# Showcase of Languages

Tags: showcase

> #### Notes
>
> - This thread is open and unlocked only because [the community decided to make an exception](http://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10656/12012). Please **do not** use this question as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. Please **do not** create additional [showcase](/questions/tagged/showcase) questions.
> - This is no longer a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), nor are snippet lengths limited by the vote tally. If you know this thread from before, please make sure you familiarize yourself with the changes.

This thread is dedicated to showing off interesting, useful, obscure, and/or unique features your favorite programming languages have to offer. This is neither a challenge nor a competition, but a collaboration effort to showcase as many programming languages as possible as well as possible.

#### How this works

- All answers should include the name of the programming language at the top of the post, prefixed by a `#`.
- Answers may contain one (and only one) factoid, i.e., a couple of sentences without code that describe the language.
- Aside from the factoid, answers should consist of snippets of code, which can (but don't have to be) programs or functions.
- The snippets do not need to be related. In fact, snippets that are *too* related may be redundant.
- Since this is not a contest, all programming languages are welcome, whenever they were created.
- Answers that contain more than a handful of code snippets should use a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to collapse everything except the factoid and one of the snippets.
- Whenever possible, there should be only one answer per programming language. This is a community wiki, so feel free to add snippets to any answer, even if you haven't created it yourself. There is a [Stack Snippet for compressing posts](http://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10734/12012), which should mitigate the effect of the 30,000 character limit.

Answers that predate these guidelines should be edited. Please help updating them as needed.

#### Current answers, sorted alphabetically by language name

```js
$.ajax({type:"GET",url:"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/44680/answers?site=codegolf&filter=withbody",success:function(data){for(var i=0;i<data.items.length;i++){var temp=document.createElement('p');temp.innerHTML = data.items[i].body.split("\n")[0];$('#list').append('<li><a href="/a/' + data.items[i].answer_id + '">' + temp.innerText || temp.textContent + '</a>');}}})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><base href="http://codegolf.stackexchange.com"><ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Why preserve a tag for one question, is it still bad for SE to have untagged question?

Answer (score 437):

## Mathematica

You might want to read this bottom-to-top since that's the order it was written in, and some explanations will refer to previous snippets or assume explanations from further down.

The list is growing quite long. I've started to remove less interesting snippets, and I will start skipping snippets now. See the [revision history](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/44683/24) for a complete list of snippets up to 41. For some real gems, check out snippets **81**, **64**, **44**, **23**, **19**, **12** and **8**.

#### Length 143 and 144 snippets

Finally... I've been waiting for this for a while (and been golfing it for about as long, so I don't have to wait even longer). I mentioned earlier that you can also equations numerically, and that you can also solve differential equations. I wanted to show a non-trivial example of that.

Consider a double pendulum on a rod (i.e. a pendulum attached to another). Each rod has unit length and each of the two pendulum weights has unit mass. I've also used unit gravity to shorten the equation. The following 143-character snippet solves the [Lagrangian equations of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) for such a system (in terms of the pendulums' angles and angular momenta). A derivation can be found [in this PDF](http://sophia.dtp.fmph.uniba.sk/~kovacik/doublePendulum.pdf), although it's a fairly straight-forward exercise if you're familiar with Lagrangian mechanics.

It's quite unreadable, because I had to golf it down a lot:

```js
d=θ@t-φ@t;NDSolve[{#''@t==-#4#2''[t]Cos@d-##3#2'@t^2Sin@d-Sin@#@t&@@@{{θ,φ,1,.5},{φ,θ,-1,1}},θ@0==2,φ@0==1,θ'@t==φ'@t==0/.t->0},{θ,φ},{t,0,60}]
```

What's neat is that Mathematica immediately displays a miniature plot of what the solutions roughly look like:

[image]

Okay, but that's a bit lame. We want to know what the motion of the pendula actually looks like. So here is a 144-character snippet, which animates the pendula while tracing out the trajectory of the lower pendulum:

```js
Graphics@{Line@{{0,0},p=θ~(h={Sin@#@#2,-Cos@#@#2}&)~t,p+φ~h~t},White,{0,0}~Circle~2.2}~Show~ParametricPlot[θ~h~u+φ~h~u,{u,0,t}]~Animate~{t,0,60}
```

The resulting animation looks like this:

[image]

<sup>I had to cheat slightly: if you plot beyond `t = 30`, the `ParametricPlot` by default uses too few plot points and the line becomes quite jagged. But most of the interesting dynamics happen after that time, so I used the option `PlotPoints -> 200` to make the second half of the animation looks smoother. It's nothing substantially different, and the first half would look indistinguishable anyway.</sup>

I think this will be my last snippet, unless I come up with something really mindblowing. Hope you enjoyed this!

#### Length 100 snippet

```js
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[Opacity[0.5]], NightHemisphere[]}, GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["ReliefMap"]]
```

I was thinking about some nice `Geo` functions for the 100 snippet, but ultimately I found something really nifty on [Tweet-a-Program](https://twitter.com/wolframtap/status/559290929316909056/photo/1), which I just had to steal. The above generates a very nice looking sun map of the Earth for the current time and day, by overlaying a semi-opaque shape of the night hemisphere over a relief map:

[image]

#### Length 81 snippet

```js
CellularAutomaton[{{0,2,3,If[0<Count[#,1,2]<3,1,3]}[[#[[2,2]]+1]]&,{},{1,1}},i,n]
```

I promise that's the last cellular automaton. But that right there is [Wireworld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireworld) in 81 characters. This time I didn't encode the rule in a single number, a) because I think it would be ridiculously huge (I didn't bother figuring it out) and b) to show you yet another usage of `CellularAutomaton`. This time, the rule is simply specified as a pure function, which receives a cells neighbourhood and returns the cell's new value. This is a much more feasible approach for cellular automata with more than 2 colours/states.

Anyway, I've set up the example from Wikipedia in `i` (two clocks generating signals, and a XOR gate) and let it run for some 50 steps:

[image]

If you're interested, the actual plotting and animation could have been snippet 77:

```js
ListAnimate[ArrayPlot[#,ColorRules->{0->Black,1->Blue,2->Red,3->Yellow}]&/@w]
```

#### Length 69 snippet

```js
DSolve[r^2*R''[r]+2r*R'[r]-R[r]==0&&(R[r]==1&&R'[r]==2/.r->1),R[r],r]
```

Back to something useful. Apart from normal systems of equations, Mathematica can also solve systems of differential equations. The above is technically just one differential equation with boundary conditions, but you can also supply that as a system of three equations. Similar to the integrating functions `DSolve` is for exact solutions whereas `NDSolve` will solve the system numerically. The above yields a single solution

```js
{{R[r] -> 1/2 r^(-(1/2) - Sqrt[5]/2) (1 - Sqrt[5] + r^Sqrt[5] + Sqrt[5] r^Sqrt[5])}}
```

which could now be easily used for further computations or plotted.

#### Length 64 snippet

```js
CellularAutomaton[{224,{2,{{2,2,2},{2,1,2},{2,2,2}}},{1,1}},i,n]
```

I promised you more `CellularAutomaton` magic! This snippet computes [Conways' Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Life) with initial condition `i` for `n` steps and gives you the result for all intermediate timesteps.

A few words about the parameters: `2` is the number of cell states. `{{2,2,2},{2,1,2},{2,2,2}}` gives the weights for the 9 cells in the 3x3 neighbourhood. It ensures that the cell itself is distinguishable from the sum of the 8 neighbours. `{1,1}` says that the CA rule depends on cells 1 step away in either direction. Finally, `224` is the actual updating rule encoded in a single number. Figuring out this number can be a bit tricky, but there's a [fairly useful tutorial in the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CellularAutomata.html). For more complicated automata, a single number won't cut it (because the number would be huge). Maybe we'll get there tomorrow! ;)

Anyway, if I feed a random grid into `i` and 200 into `n`, and send the result through an animated `ArrayPlot`, we can see that it's actually working:

[image]

#### Length 59 snippet

```js
SphericalPlot3D[Re[Sin[θ]Cos[θ]Exp[2I*φ]],{θ,0,π},{φ,0,2π}]
```

Remember the polar plot from snippet 26? We can do the same thing in 3D! (In fact, there are two functions: `RevolutionPlot3D` for cylindrical polars and `SphericalPlot3D` for spherical polars.) Just like `Graphics3D` all three-dimensional plots are automatically rotatable in Mathematica, so you don't have to worry about a good camera angle upfront. The above plots something like a spherical harmonic (not quite though) and looks like:

[image]

#### Length 52 snippet

```js
Manipulate[Plot[x^2a+x*b,{x,-3,3}],{a,.1,3},{b,0,3}]
```

This one is pretty nifty. `Manipulate` takes *any* expression, parameterises it with a bunch of variables, and then gives you a widget, where you can tweak the parameters and see live how the expression changes. As an expression you'll usually have some kind of plot. This is particularly useful if you're using Mathematica in lectures to demonstrate how families of solutions respond to modifying the parameters. The above shows how the `a` and `b` coefficients scale and shift a parabola:

[image]

#### Length 48 snippet

```js
Import["http://www.google.com/doodles","Images"]
```

`Import` is a pretty powerful command. It's used both for loading files from disc and from the web. It knows quite a lot of different file formats, and for some of them (like HTML pages) it can actually extract data right away. The above downloads all images from Google's doodle page.

#### Length 45 snippet

```js
EdgeDetect@ExampleData@{"TestImage","Splash"}
```

Time for some image processing. Mathematica comes with a whole bunch of example data, including images (like Lena), textures, 3D models and audio snippets. First, we load one of those:

[image]

Want to detect edges? It's a single function call:

[image]

#### Length 44 snippet

```js
ArrayPlot@CellularAutomaton[110,{{1},0},100]
```

Finally, I've got enough characters to use `CellularAutomaton` and also render the result. :) As far as I'm aware, `CellularAutomaton` is the only function in Mathematica related to CAs. But Stephen Wolfram seems to consider himself number-one guy when it comes to cellular automata, so this function is incredibly powerful. The above shows pretty much its simplest usage. This simulates a 1D cellular automaton for 100 steps - and it will actually return the state of the automaton at each of those steps, so the result is two-dimensional. The rule is the first parameter, which can either be specified in detail via lists, or just encoded in a single number. For this example, I've chosen the rather famous, Turing complete, [Rule 110](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110). `{{1},0}` defines the initial condition: a single `1` in front of a background of zeroes. Maybe I'll show off some more features of `CellularAutomaton` in the future when I've got more characters available: it can simulate CAs in higher dimensions, using larger neighbourhoods and with more than two states.

`ArrayPlot` is another nice plotting utility which just plots a 2D list as a grid of solid colours indicating their value. In the simplest case, `0` is mappend to white and `1` to black. The result of the snippet is:

[image]

#### Length 43 snippet

```js
HighlightGraph[graph,FindVertexCover@graph]
```

It's been a while since I mentioned graphs. There a lot of common graph theoretical problems built-in Mathematica, along with nice visualisation tools. The above, for a given `graph`, will find a minimal vertex cover of the graph, and then render the graph with those vertices highlighed. E.g. if `graph` is `PetersenGraph[7,2]` back from snippet 18, we get:

[image]

#### Length 42 snippet

```js
Animate[Plot[Sin[t-x],{x,0,10}], {t,0,10}]
```

It's pretty simple to animate things in Mathematica (and they don't even have to be images). You just give it the expression to be evaluated for each frame and a bunch of parameters that should vary over the frames. The above simply animates a plot of a moving sine wave. The animation will look something like the following GIF:

[image]

#### Length 40 snippet

```js
SortBy[PlanetData[#, "EscapeVelocity"]&]
```

`SortBy` does what you expect: it sorts a list based on values obtained by mapping a given function onto each list element. But wait, the above call doesn't contain a list at all. Since Mathematica 10, there is support for *currying* or *partial application* for some functions. This is not a language feature like in the more purist functional languages, but is just implemented manually for a whole bunch of functions where this is often useful. It means that the above snippet returns a new function, which *only* takes a list and then sorts by the given function. This can be very useful if this sorting order is something you'll use more often throughout your code.

And yes, there's another nice `*Data` function - the above will sort planet names by the planets' [escape velocities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity).

#### Length 39 snippet

```js
f[1]=1
f[2]=1
f[n_]:=f[n]=f[n-1]+f[n-2]
```

I promised to make the Fibonacci function more efficient. This snippet shows how trivial memoisation is in Mathematica. Note that all that's changed is an additional `f[n]=` in the third line. So when `f` is called for a new value (say `f[3]`), then `f[3]=f[3-1]+f[3-2]` will be evaluated. This computes `f[2]+f[1]`, then assigns it to `f[3]` (with `=`, not with `:=`!), and ultimately returns the value for our initial call. So calling this function adds a new definition for this value, which is obviously more specific than the general rule - and hence will be used for all future calls to `f` with that value.

Remember that the other Fibonacci function took 4 seconds for 30 values? This needs 3 seconds for 300,000 values.

#### Length 37 snippet

```js
l//.{a___,x_,b___,x_,c___}:>{a,x,b,c}
```

In the last snippet I mentioned patterns. These are most often used in *rules*, which (among other things) can be used to modify structures which match a certain pattern. So let's look at this snippet.

`{a___,x_,b___,x_,c___}:>{a,x,b,c}` is a rule. `x_` with a single underscore is a pattern which refers to a single arbitrary value (which could itself be a list or similar). `a___` is a *sequence* pattern (see also snippet 15), which refers to a sequence of 0 or more values. Note that I'm using `x_` twice, which means that those two parts of the list have to be the same value. So this pattern matches any list which contains a value twice, calls that element `x` and calls the three sequences around those two elements `a`, `b` and `c`. This is replaced by `{a,x,b,c}` - that is the second `x` is dropped.

Now `//.` will apply a rule until the pattern does not match any more. So the above snippet removes all duplicates from a list `l`. However, it's a bit more powerful than that: `//.` applies the rule at all levels. So if `l` itself contains lists (to any depth), duplicates from those sublists will also be removed.

#### Length 36 snippet

```js
f[1]=1
f[2]=1
f[n_]:=f[n-1] + f[n-2]
```

Time for new language features! Mathematica has a few nice things about defining functions. For a start, you can supply multiple function definitions for the same name, for different numbers or types of arguments. You can use *patterns* to describe which sorts of arguments a definition applies to. Furthermore, you can even add definitions for single values. Mathematica will then pick the most specific applicable definition for any function call, and leave undefined calls unevaluated. This allows (among other things) to write recursive functions in a much more natural way than using an `If` switch for the base case.

Another thing to note about the above snippet is that I'm using both `=` and `:=`. The difference is that the right-hand side of `=` is evaluated only once, at the time of the definition, whereas `:=` is re-evaluated each time the left-hand side is referred to. In fact `:=` even works when assigning variables, which will then have a dynamic value.

So the above, of course, is just a Fibonacci function. And a very inefficient one at that. Computing the first 30 numbers takes some 4 seconds on my machine. We'll see shortly how we can improve the performance without even having to get rid of the recursive definition.

#### Length 35 snippet

```js
StreamPlot[{x^2,y},{x,0,3},{y,0,3}]
```

A very neat plot, which outputs the streamlines of a 2D vector field. This is similar to a normal vector plot, in that each arrow is tangent to the vector field. However, the arrows aren't placed on a fix grid but joined up into lines (the streamlines). The significance of these lines is that they indicate the trajectory of a particle (in a fluid, say) if the vector field was a velocity field. The above input looks like:

[image]

#### Length 34 snippet

```js
Solve[a*x^4+b*x^3+c*x^2+d*x==0, x]
```

Mathematica can also solve equations (or systems of equations, but we've only got so many characters right now). The result will, as usual, be symbolic.

```js
{
  {x -> 0}, 
  {x -> -(b/(3 a)) - (2^(1/3) (-b^2 + 3 a c))/(3 a (-2 b^3 + 9 a b c - 27 a^2 d + Sqrt[4 (-b^2 + 3 a c)^3 + (-2 b^3 + 9 a b c - 27 a^2 d)^2])^(1/3)) + (-2 b^3 + 9 a b c - 27 a^2 d + Sqrt[4 (-b^2 + 3 a c)^3 + (-2 b^3 + 9 a b c - 27 a^2 d)^2])^(1/3)/(3 2^(1/3) a)}, 
  {x -> -(b/(3 a)) + ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (-b^2 + 3 a c))/(3 2^(2/3) a (-2 b^3 + 9 a b c - 27 a^2 d + Sqrt[4 (-b^2 + 3 a c)^3 + (-2 b^3 + 9 a b c - 27 a^2 d)^2])^(1/3)) - ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-2 b^3 + 9 a b c - 27 a^2 d + Sqrt[4 (-b^2 + 3 a c)^3 + (-2 b^3 + 9 a b c - 27 a^2 d)^2])^(1/3))/(6 2^(1/3) a)}, 
  {x -> -(b/(3 a)) + ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-b^2 + 3 a c))/(3 2^(2/3) a (-2 b^3 + 9 a b c - 27 a^2 d + Sqrt[4 (-b^2 + 3 a c)^3 + (-2 b^3 + 9 a b c - 27 a^2 d)^2])^(1/3)) - ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (-2 b^3 + 9 a b c - 27 a^2 d + Sqrt[4 (-b^2 + 3 a c)^3 + (-2 b^3 + 9 a b c - 27 a^2 d)^2])^(1/3))/( 6 2^(1/3) a)}
}
```

Note that the solutions are given as *rules*, which I'll probably show in more detail in some future snippet.

#### Length 33 snippet

```js
Dynamic@EdgeDetect@CurrentImage[]
```

Thanks to benwaffle for this idea. `CurrentImage[]` loads the current image of your webcam. `EdgeDetect` turns an image into a black-and-white image where edges are white and the rest is black (see snippet 45 for an example). The real fun comes with `Dynamic` which makes the expression update itself. So the result of this will actually stream pictures from your webcam and do live edge detection on them.

#### Length 32 snippet

```js
NumberLinePlot[x^2<2^x,{x,-2,5}]
```

A rather unusual type of plot. It can plot a bunch of different things along the number line, like points and intervals. You can also give it condition, and it will show you the region where that condition is true:

[image]

The arrow indicates that the region continues to infinity. The white circles indicate that those are open intervals (the end points are not part of the interval). For closed ends, the circles would be filled.

#### Length 28 snippet

```js
Graphics3D@{Sphere[],Cone[]}
```

Time for some 3D graphics. The above renders a super-imposed sphere and cone with default parameters, which looks something like crystal ball:

[image]

In Mathematica, you can actually click and drag this little widget to rotate it.

#### Length 27 snippet

```js
CountryData["ITA", "Shape"]
```

More `*Data`! `CountryData` is pretty crazy. Getting the shape of a country is not even the tip of the iceberg. There is so much data about countries, you could probably write an entire book about this function. Like... there is `FemaleLiteracyFraction`. You can also query that data for different points in time. [For a full list, see the reference.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountryData.html)

[image]

#### Length 26 snippet

```js
PolarPlot[Sin[5θ],{θ,0,π}]
```

Time for a more interesting plot. `PolarPlot` is simply a plot in polar coordinates. Instead of specifying y for a given x, you specify a radius r for a given angle θ:

[image]

#### Length 25 snippet

```js
{{1,5},{2,3},{7,4}}.{8,9}
```

We've finally got enough characters for some vector maths. The above computes the matrix multiplication of a 2x3 matrix and row 2-vector:

```js
{53, 43, 92}
```

#### Length 23 snippet

```js
Rotate[Rectangle, Pi/2]
```

Heh. Hehe. You think you know what this does. But you don't. `Rectangle` by itself is just a named function. To actually get an object representing a rectangle, you'd need to call that function with some parameters. So what do you think happens, when you try to rotate `Rectangle`? This:

[image]

#### Length 22 snippet

```js
30~ElementData~"Color"
```

Another of the built-in `*Data` functions. Yes, for chemical elements, you don't just get things like their atomic number, melting point and name... you can actually get their colour at room temperature. The above gives the colour of Zinc:

```js
SlateGray
```

#### Length 21 snippet

```js
Integrate[E^(-x^2),x]
```

We had differentiation some time ago. Time for integration. Mathematica can handle both definite and indefinite integrals. In particular, `Integrate` will give you an exact solution, and it can deal with a ton of standard integrals and integration techniques (for numerical results, there's `NIntegrate`). If you know your calculus, you'll have noticed that the above Gaussian integral doesn't actually have a closed form indefinite integral... unless you consider the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) closed form, that is. Mathematica returns:

```js
1/2 Sqrt[π] Erf[x]
```

#### Length 20 snippet

```js
"Sun"~StarData~"Age"
```

Back to built-in *data*. There must be at least two dozen `*Data` functions for everything you could possibly think of. Each of them takes an identifier for the thing you want the data for, and a property (or list of properties) to retrieve. The above is just one of the shortest you can get with `Sun`, `Star` and `Age` all being pretty short, because I couldn't wait to show this feature.

Oh yeah, and did I mention that Mathematica (since 9) supports quantities with units? (More on that later.) The above evaluates to:

```js
Quantity[4.57*10^9, "Years"]
```

which is displayed as

[image]

#### Length 19 snippet

```js
MandelbrotSetPlot[]
```

Yeah... very useful function... I use it *all* the time. (Sometimes, their desire to support anything that's possibly computable might go a bit far...)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In their defence, the function is a bit more useful than that: you can give it a particular section of the graph you want to plot.

#### Length 18 snippet

```js
PetersenGraph[7,2]
```

Since Mathematica 8, it understands what graph are, so it comes with all sorts of graph-theory related functions. And it wasn't Mathematica if it wouldn't include a ton of built-ins. The above generates the graph data for a generalised [Petersen graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph). It does produce the actual data structure that can be manipulated, but Mathematica immediately displays that graph data ... graphically:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Length 17 snippet

```js
Plot[x^x,{x,0,2}]
```

Finally enough characters to do some plotting. The above is really just the simplest example of a one-dimensional plot. I promise to show off cooler plots later on

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Length 15 snippet

```js
{##4,#,#2,#3}&
```

This shows two of the more powerful features (and also useful ones for golfing). The entire thing is an unnamed *pure function*, comparable with `lambda`s in Python, or Procs in Ruby. Pure function are simply terminated by a `&`. This operator has very low precedence, so that it usually includes almost everything left of it. The arguments of a pure function are referred to with `#`, sometimes followed by other things. The first argument is `#` or `#1`, the second is `#2`, and so on.

The other feature is `Sequence`s. These are basically like splats in other languages. A sequence is like list without the list around it - it's literally just a sequence of values, which can be used in lists, function arguments etc. `##` in particular is a sequence of all pure-function arguments. `##2` is a sequence of all arguments starting from the second. So if we named the above function `f`, and called it like

```js
f[1,2,3,4,5]
```

We would get

```js
{4,5,1,2,3}
```

so the function rotates the input arguments 3 elements to the left. Note that `##4` referred to `4,5` which were flattened into the list.

#### Length 12 snippet

```js
D[x^y^x,x,y]
```

Partial differentiation. `D` will differentiate the first expression successively with respect to its other arguments, giving you a symbolic expression as the result. So the above is *d²(x^y^x)/dxdy* (where the *d*s are partial), which Mathematica reports to be

```js
x^y^x (y^(-1 + x) + y^(-1 + x) Log[x] + x y^(-1 + x) Log[x] Log[y]) + 
  x^(1 + y^x) y^(-1 + x) Log[x] (y^x/x + y^x Log[x] Log[y])
```

#### Length 9 snippet

```js
Exp[I*Pi]
```

We haven't done any complex arithmetic yet! As you can see, `π` was actually just an alias for `Pi`. Anyway, the above will actually correctly return the *integer* `-1`.

#### Length 8 snippet

```js
Sunset[]
```

Yeah. Talk about crazy built-ins. Without parameters that actually gives you a datetime object of the next sunset at your current location. It also takes parameters for other dates, other locations etc. Here is what it looks like for me right now:

[image]

#### Length 7 snippet

```js
9!/43!!
```

This snippet shows off a few cool things.

Mathematica doesn't just have a built-in factorial operator `!`, it also has a double factorial `!!` (which multiplies every other number from `n` down to `1`). Furthermore, it supports arbitrary-precision integers. The `43!!` will be evaluated exactly, down to the last digit. Furthermore, rational numbers will also be evaluated exactly. So, since both numerator and denominator in there are integers, Mathematica will reduce the fractions as far as possible and then present you with

```js
128/198893132162463319205625
```

Of course, you can use floats whenever you want, but in general, if your input doesn't contain floats, your result will be exact.

#### Length 4 snippet

```js
Here
```

It's about time we started with Mathematica's wealth of crazy built-ins. The above does what it says on the tin and (for me) evaluates to `GeoPosition[{51.51, -0.09}]`.

#### Length 3 snippet

```js
x-x
```

Just to showcase the original *Factoid*: the above works even if `x` is not defined yet and will actually result in `0` in that case.

#### Length 2 snippet

```js
3x
```

Multiplication via juxtaposition! If it's clear that an identifier ends and another begins, you don't need a `*` or even whitespace to multiply them together. This works with pretty much everything, including strings and variables that don't have values yet. Very convenient for golfing. ;)

#### Length 1 snippet

```js
π
```

Guess what, it's Pi. And in fact, it's not some approximate floating-point representation, it's Pi exactly - so all sorts of complex and trigonometric functions this is used in will yield exact results if they are known.

#### Factoid

Mathematica can perform symbolic manipulation, so variables don't need values to work with them.

Comment: Awesome though the Sunset function may be, the time it actually returns these days makes me very sad.

Comment: RE 22 : Chemestrica

Comment: Snippet 23 is quite curious. If you did `Translate[Scale[Rectangle, 80], {0, 0, 100}]` would the huge word `Rectangle` appear floating in front of your monitor?

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Just tried it... picked an unfortunate `z` offset... smacked me right in the face.

Comment: Can you prettify the code? Probably with `<!-- language-all: lang-js -->` since Mathematica isn't supported except on mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MartinButtner At least the functions would be a different color.

Comment: @mbomb007 Just tested it, it looks fairly reasonable.

Comment: I wonder how long would be a snippet that searches for a random snippet inside `Neat Examples` section from Wolfram Documentation :)

Comment: I assume the next patch will have `MathematicaData["Examples",Length]`

Comment: The official Mathematica website should absolutely link to this.

Comment: How can you have an exact value for Pi?

Comment: @durron597 By keeping it as a symbol and making all your trigonometric and complex functions aware of what to do with a π.

Comment: Once I saw that the legendary Martin Büttner had posted a Mathematica answer, I knew I had no chance at winning a popularity contest. You sir are a true wizard.

Comment: `GeoGraphics[]` would be nice for the missing length 13 I think. Show a high quality map of your current location :D

Comment: @Calle Heh, I actually considered that ... I might use it for something more advanced for a longer snippet. There's a deleted length-13 snippet in the revision history.

Comment: Many long snippets are missing!

Comment: @Caridorc Sorry, I've sunk a lot of time into this over the past week so I took a bit of a break. I think this answer still has more snippets than any other though. ;) And I'll probably add a couple more if I come up with nice ideas that are actually more interesting than what I already have.

Comment: @Martin Butter Awesome,thank you for the dedication! :)

Comment: Nicely done! Have you went through [**TaP**](https://twitter.com/wolframtap) ?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Oh, I didn't know that. Thank you! I might have a look for something for 100 and ~120. I've got something up my sleeve for 150, but I can't seem to get an interesting version of it for any less than that.

Comment: You may also look at [NEW-IN-X](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10) stuff, other X - adjust URL accordingly - can find some wonderful stuff there.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Found something on TaP which I wanted to look into anyway. I'll have a look around the new-in-x as well. Thanks again!

Comment: Grats on achieving more +1's than the question itself!

Comment: I believe `Dynamic@EdgeDetect@CurrentImage[]` is a 33 character live webcam edge detector

Comment: @benwaffle Neat! That is actually really nifty, I'll probably include that later.

Comment: Now I need to learn Mathematica. Nice post!

Comment: Wow, if Mathematica can do all this, why do still people in academia keep insisting to use Matlab?

Comment: @vsz I actually had to use SageMath with Python.

Comment: I believe that [this](http://pastebin.com/dU6hUwZD) number I calculated (using Mathematica with nearly all my RAM) would be the rule number for Wireworld.

Comment: Zero starting point isn't necessary in `NDSolve` and `Animate`, you can save two characters in both snippets with `{t,60}`. Also you can use `θ'@0 == φ'@0 == 0` without `t->0`. Unfortunately, you didn't assign anything to θ and φ, so animation doesn't work without modification of the code.

Comment: Time for a length 275 snippet. :D

Comment: Can you update it with up to 282?

Comment: _But Stephen Wolfram seems to consider himself number-one guy when it comes to cellular automata_ I laughed a lot with this sentence :-)

Comment: I still can't get over that syntax

Comment: What do the `@` signs mean? E.g. in `Graphics3D@{}`

Comment: @Cyoce it's syntactic sugar for `Graphics3D[{}]`, so it's just calling a function with a single argument.

Comment: @MartinBüttner cool! Kind of weird, but definitely useful for golfing.

Comment: @Cyoce Also useful for maintainability and readability in actual code. When you just want to apply a bunch of function to an expression you can just prepend `f @ g @ h @ expr` without having to worry about counting off the right amount of `]` to add after `expr`. Mathematica goes even further there and also allows postfix function application (which is useless of golfing though) so the code reads in the order it's run, e.g. `expr // h // g // f` for the above example.

Comment: @MartinBüttner huh. That's even cooler. And stranger :P

Comment: @MartinBüttner Did you buy Mathematica for golfing?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere I have a free licence through my university. (And I also own a Raspberry Pi which is probably the cheapest way to get a Mathematica licence otherwise.)

Comment: That was very interesting too read. Mathematica sometimes seem to have a built-in for almost anything. Btw, "I think this will be my last snippet, unless I come up with something really mindblowing. Hope you enjoyed this!" Have you come up with something really mindblowing? It can be up to 325 bytes long. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I was considering doing something for 300 but it wouldn't have been *that* novel and I kinda missed that window. Maybe for 400, who knows. No guarantees though. ;)

Comment: Now that you have 344 upvotes, you should come up with something really mindblowing ;P We are all waiting.

Comment: This might be the longest and most elaborate answer on this site.

Answer (score 200):

## The Infamous [Shakespeare Programming Language](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Shakespeare)

Shakespeare Programming Language was created in 2001 by two Swedish students, Karl Hasselström and Jon Åslund, and it combines, as the [authors proclaim](http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net/report/shakespeare/#SECTION00030000000000000000),

> the expressiveness of BASIC with the user-friendliness of assembly language.

Answers go from top to bottom. Also, it's common to see me refer to older or previous snippets.

([link for myself: edit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/44766/edit))

**Factoid:**

Shakespeare's code resembles, as one would expect, a Shakespeare play, where the variables are characters on the play and their value changes as they are "insulted" or praised".

**Length 1 snippet:**

```spl
I
```

Shakespeare's code is divided in Acts, and the acts are themselves divided in Scenes, for "jump-to" causalities. Defining an Act as `Act I` means that it will be the first piece of the code to be run, per example - but not only.

**Length 2 snippet:**

```spl
as
```

Used in a comparative between two "characters".

**Length 3 snippet:**

```spl
day
```

By now, you may be getting the feeling that SPL is very verbose. And weird. And you've seen nothing yet. `day`, in SPL, is 1. All "positive" and "neutral" nouns are considered as `1`, as well as all "negative" ones are `-1`.

**Length 4 snippet:**

```spl
rich
```

What is `rich`? An adjective. In SPL, adjectives make the value of the noun they're attached to multiply by two. See implementation on snippet 14.

**Length 5 snippet:**

```spl
Act I
```

Implementation of the first snippet. All acts may be given a title, such as `Act I: Hamlet must die!`, since everything after the Roman numeral is ignored by the parser.

**Length 6 snippet:**

```spl
better
```

Every language has conditions, and SPL is no exception. Except, since this is a language with a lengthy syntax (and did I mentioned it to be weird?), its conditional statements are going to be long. Having Ophelia ask Juliet `Am I better than you?` is like having `if (Ophelia > Juliet)` on most "normal" languages. And, of course, you can ask the other way around: `Am I not better than you?` is the equivalent of `if (Ophelia < Juliet)`. And you can already guess how the `=` is translated to SPL: `as good as` - usage of code snippet 2.

However, `good/better` is not the only way to make comparisons in this shakesperian language, you can use any adjective. The same principle of snippet 3 applies here as well, with "positive" adjectives having the value `>`, while "negative" ones mean `<`.

**Length 7 snippet:**

```spl
Juliet:
```

This is the invocation of a variable; after this, his/her instructions/declarations/whatever will follow.

A limitation of SPL is that it has a limited number of variables: Romeo, Juliet, Hamlet, Ophelia, MacBeth and so on are a few examples of "characters" that will appear on a Shakesperian program.

**Length 8 snippet:**

```spl
[Exeunt]
```

`[Exeunt]` is placed when all "characters" leave the "stage". Hopefully I can elaborate a bit more later on about the interaction between characters. Generally is the last instruction of any SPL program, although `[Exeunt]` isn't specifically the terminal "character" of the language. For another example, see snippet 27.

**Length 9 snippet:**

```spl
as bad as
```

Nine characters just to represent a mere `=` - using snippet 2. Have I mentioned that SPL is weird? See snippet 30 for examples.
(and yes, there's more than one way to output it)

**Length 10 snippet:**

```spl
difference
```

A fancy way of representing `-`, a subtraction. You can have math operations on SPL, even though you'll probably need a full day to get it right.

**Factoid**
*(since I managed somehow to reach ten snippets of code, let's take a bit of a break and have another factoid about SPL)*

If you want to run your shakesperian code in all its glory, there's [this site](https://shakespearelang.org/) - I'm still testing it, since I discovered it not even five minutes ago. There's also a way to translate it to C using [a translator](http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net/report/shakespeare/#SECTION00070000000000000000).

Another site for running SPL code is [this one](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=SPL) that works by internally translating the SPL code to another esoteric language: Oracle PL/SQL.

**Length 11 snippet:**

```spl
[Exit Romeo]
```

Yes! At last I can talk about the interaction between characters! In order to have its value changed or to interact with others, a "character" must be on stage - entering with `[Enter Romeo]`. If a character is addressed to but is not present, there's a runtime error and the program stops. Because, in SPL, the value of the variables is set by the amount of names they're praised with - or insulted with - by the other characters on stage. I feel that I should put an example to clear some confusion my lame explanation may create, but perhaps it's best to delay that a few snippets.

**Length 12 snippet:**

```spl
Remember me.
```

SPL is pretty "basic", alright - but it has stacks! When, per instance, Romeo tells Juliet to "remember him", he's actually telling his loved one to push the Romeo's value into her stack. Popping the value is done with `Recall your happy childhood!`, or `Recall your love for me`, or basically any sentence that begins with `Recall` - the rest is just artistic drivel, like snippet 22.

**Length 13 snippet**

```spl
Let us return
```

The Shakesperian way of having a `goto`. And this is where the Acts and Scenes come in handy. If Romeo tells Juliet `we shall return to Act II` (yes, again, there are multiple ways of write it), the program will jump to that specific part of the code. It's also seen alongside conditional statements.

**Length 14 snippet**

```spl
my little pony
```

Yes, it was a series back in the 80s. Here, it's `2*1`. Why? Because a `pony` is a (somewhat) positive noun and `little` is an adjective. So, remembering snippets 3 and 4, we have `little = "2 *"` and `pony = "1"`.

**Length 15 snippet**

```spl
Speak thy mind!
```

In a SPL program, you'll see this (or `Speak your mind!`, which is the same) *a lot*. This basically outputs the value of each "character" in digit, letter or anything else, depending on the character set being used by your computer. There's also `Open your mind.` that does almost the same thing, albeit only outputting in numeric form.

**Length 16 snippet**

```spl
You are nothing!
```

When someone tells you this in real life, you'll feel depressed. When Ophelia tells this to Hamlet in Shakespearian programming, Hamlet feels worthless. What does this mean? That `Hamlet = 0`.

**Length 17 snippet**

```spl
Ophelia, a wench.
```

In a screenplay, before the actual play starts, the characters must be presented. In most programming languages, the variables must also be declared before use. Seeing that SPL is a programming language that resembles a screenplay, this is how you declare its variables, by stating which are the ones appearing during the program.

But what does "a wench" mean? Does it mean that it's a specific (and cool) data type name? Well... I hate to disappoint you, but it means nothing: everything after the comma is disregarded by the parser, meaning you can put there the most outrageous drivel you can think of.

**Length 18 snippet**

```spl
lying sorry coward
```

`-4` for all earthly creatures. Why? Because `2*2*(-1) = -4`.

**Length 19 snippet**

```spl
Romeo:
 Remember me.
```

At last!!! I can finally output a full correct syntax instruction (albeit a short one)! This is how you use snippet 12: firstly you declare who's talking, then on the next line you write the "dialogue". Normally, only two "characters" are on stage, to avoid making the parser sad and confused. When you need another "character", you take one from the stage and replace him by the new one.

**Length 20 snippet**

```spl
cube of thy codpiece
```

I wanted to elaborate a bit more for this one, but, truth be told, the things I come up with are still too short for this snippet length. And, so, I bring you this, which ends up being `-1` - because (-1)<sup>3</sup> = -1 (and `codpiece` is a "negative" noun, since they're uncomfortable and all). SPL understands a few more elaborate arithmetic operations as *some* exponentiation and square roots.

**Factoid** *(yet another one, since we've reached another milestone)*

The "Hello World Program" in Shakesperian has 89 lines and more than 2400 characters long, [as seen here](http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net/report/shakespeare/#SECTION00091000000000000000).

**Length 21 snippet**

```spl
Listen to your heart.
```

In snippet 15 you outputted something; here, you input a number to the program. If you want to input a character, you'll use `Open your mind.` instead. And, needless to say, this value will be stored in the "character" being spoken to.

**Length 22 snippet**

```spl
Recall your childhood!
```

Popping an integer from a stack is done with this, as explained on snippet 12. When, per instance, Ophelia tells Hamlet the aforementioned sentence, it causes Hamlet to take an integer from his stack and assume that value.

Of course that, as long as the word `recall` is starting the sentence, you can fill in the rest with pretty much anything your creative shakesperian mind desires.

**Length 23 snippet**

```spl
Are you better than me?
```

Implementation of snippet 6. When a "character" makes a question like this to another, what he/she is doing is equivalent to `if (x > y)` on more common programming languages. The follow-up of this instruction must be delayed until I have more characters available.

**Length 24 snippet**

```spl
[Enter Romeo and Juliet]
```

Yes, "characters" may enter in pairs. It's not required to have one "character" entering the stage, being followed by another.

**Length 25 snippet**

```spl
remainder of the quotient
```

25 characters just to write a `%`. 25 characters to have the remainder of a division. And to use it? Well, that's even bigger - see snippet 75.

**Length 26 snippet**

```spl
Let us return to scene II.
```

Here it is, a `goto` in SPL, which works as one would expect in a programming language. A thing is: you can jump between scenes in the same act, and between acts; but you cannot jump between scenes in different acts.

**Length 27 snippet**

```spl
[Exeunt Ophelia and Hamlet]
```

When more than one "character" leave the stage, instead of `Exit`, and keeping in tradition with SPL's theatrical nature, the latin word "Exeunt" is used. Sometimes it can be replaced just by snippet 8.

**Length 28 snippet**

```spl
Scene I: Ophelia's flattery.
```

Declaring a Scene. As you can already expect if you've been coping with me, the important bit is the `Scene I`, the rest is artistic fluff.

There have been some compilers made (like [this one that compiles from SPL to C, written in Python](https://github.com/drsam94/Spl)) that instead refer to the text after the numbering of the Act/Scene. While more logical (after all, during a play, having the characters saying lines such as "let us return to Act I" may be deemed silly), I'm sticking to the original way.

**Length 29 snippet**

```spl
You pretty little warm thing!
```

Yes, yet another constant (since we need *way more* characters to have arithmetic operations). This one is equal to `8`, because `2*2*2*1 = 8`.

**Length 30 snippet**

```spl
You are as cowardly as Hamlet!
```

Saying this to, per instance, Romeo, means that `Romeo = Hamlet`. Like snippet 9.

**Factoid** *(yes, another landmark reached!)*

This language was created for an assignment in a Syntax Analysis course - thus, no SPL compiler was created by the authors. More: it seems SPL's authors have severed their ties with their creation, since nothing appears to have been modified in the language since 2001...

**Length 31 snippet**

```spl
Am I as horrid as a flirt-gill?
```

Yes, I know, it's somewhat repeating snippet 23, although, here, we're comparing the "character" who speaks with a "flirt-gill" (of, if you prefer, `if (Ophelia == -1)`). The thing is...

**Length 32 snippet**

```spl
If so, let us return to scene I.
```

... now I can introduce the `then` of SPL, and the conditional jump-to, and the Shakesperian way of implementing loops. You can, per instance, make Romeo assume the value `0`, increment his value while doing some other task and stop when he reaches 10, proceeding with the program afterwards.

**Length 33 snippet**

```spl
If not, let us return to scene I.
```

Just a reminder that, instead, we can instead proceed forward to another scene if the condition we tested for *is false*.

**Length 34 snippet**

```spl
Open your mind! Remember yourself.
```

Two instructions in a row, yippie! The first one reads a character, the second one pushes it into the other character's memory stack.

**Length 35 snippet**

```spl
Act I: Death!

Scene I: Oh, shit.
```

The proper way of declaring an Act and a Scene. Add artistic mush tastefully.

**Length 36 snippet**

```spl
Thou art as sweet as a summer's day!
```

Another way of saying that the "character" being spoken to will receive the value `1` - because summer's days are nice and pleasant.

**Length 37 snippet**

```spl
Art thou more cunning than the Ghost?
```

Ophelia asking this question to Hamlet means, translating this to a less readable programming language, `if (Hamlet > the Ghost)`. It's snippet 23 all over again, yeah - but it goes to show you that it's not required to ask the "characters" if they are better than each other: any other question will work too.

**Length 38 snippet**

```spl
[Enter the Ghost, Romeo and the Ghost]
```

Yes, I'm calling a "character" twice - because I wanted to have the program give me an error. Calling a "character" that's already on stage, or telling one that's absent to exit, will cause great grief to the parser/compiler.

**Length 39 snippet**

```spl
the sum of a fat lazy pig and yourself!
```

The full instruction is more better looking that this, I'll give you that, but... here's our first arithmetic operation! What does it all mean, actually? Well, `pig` is a dirty animal (albeit tasty), so it's equivalent to `-1`, has two adjectives, meaning `fat lazy pig` equals `2*2*(-1) = -4`. But what about `yourself`? It's a reflexive pronoum, not a name nor an adjective. Well, remember that SPL is based on dialogues between "characters"; thus, `yourself` refers to the other "character" on stage. So, we arrive at the end and we discover that "the sum of a fat lazy pig and yourself" is, in fact, `-4 + x`.

**Length 40 snippet**

```spl
the sum of a squirrel and a white horse.
```

Yes, another sum, but this one is simpler than snippet 39. This is merely `1 + 2` - `3`, if my math is correct.

**Factoid** *(still with me after these forty snippets of artistic fluff? You deserve a prize.)*

SPL, in its version 1.2.1, can be downloaded [here](http://shakespearelang.sf.net/download/spl-1.2.1.tar.gz).

**Length 41 snippet**

```spl
Juliet:
 Speak thy mind!

[Exit Romeo]
```

Sometimes, "characters" are only called on stage to have their value changed - which, on a real play, would be something quite bizarre. Anyway, here, Juliet makes her beloved Romeo print his stored value, after which he exits the stage.

**Length 42 snippet**

```spl
Speak YOUR mind! You are as bad as Hamlet!
```

Again two instructions in one line (we can have multiple, but the snippet length doesn't allow it yet); here we have a "character" telling another to output its value and assume whichever value Hamlet has. Confusing? Mayhap.

**Length 43 snippet**

```spl
Am I as horrid as a half-witted flirt-gill?
```

Juliet asking this doesn't mean she has low-esteem (although it might in real-life); it's simply another `if`, like snippets 23 and 37. Oh, I almost forgot: this translates to `if (Juliet == -2)`.

**Length 44 snippet**

```spl
You are as evil as the square root of Romeo!
```

Yes, square roots are evil, didn't you know? Anyway, this instruction is straightforward enough to understand what it does: attributes the "character" being spoken to the value of the square root of the value stored in Romeo.

**Length 45 snippet**

```spl
Hamlet:
 Art thou more cunning than the Ghost?
```

Snippet 37 properly written with the character who's speaking the line.

**Length 46 snippet**

```spl
the product of a rural town and my rich purse.
```

Okay... anyway, SPL may be the only language in the world that allows you to multiply towns with purses. This means `(2*1)*(2*1)` which, if I'm not very mistaken, is equal to `4`.

**Length 47 snippet**

```spl
Romeo:
 Speak your mind.

Juliet:
 Speak YOUR mind!
```

I'll give you that: it may be one of the most bizarre dialogues in history. But it's what you get when you choose a weird language to showcase. Romeo and Juliet are telling each other, in short, to output their values.

**Length 48 snippet**

```spl
You lying fatherless useless half-witted coward!
```

Translating it directly, `2*2*2*2*(-1)`. `-16`, right?

**Length 49 snippet**

```spl
Scene V: Closure.

Hamlet:
 Speak your mind!

[Exeunt]
```

An example of how to terminate a program in SPL. You can declare a scene specifically for it (although it's not required), then Hamlet asks another "character" to output their value, then they all exit the stage. And yes, it's required for all of them to get off the stage.

**Length 50 snippet**

```spl
Othello, a young squire.
Lady Macbeth, an old fart.
```

More "character" presentation, before the proper instructions. As always, the only thing that matters to the compiler is `Othello` and `Lady Macbeth`, so the rest of the line is up for grabs...

One more thing: the "characters" don't have to be related to each other in order to appear in a SPL program - so you can have Romeo, Othello and Hamlet on the same play.

**Factoid** *(half-a-century of these things? Phew! After this I think I'm going to loathe William Shakespeare...)*

The SPL to C translator, mentioned a while ago and developed by the SPL creators, was based on [Flex](http://flex.sourceforge.net/) and [Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/).

**Length 51 snippet**

```spl
Othello:
 Recall your great dreams. Speak your mind!
```

*(So sick of Romeo, Juliet and Hamlet... let's bring in Othello, for a change!)*

`Recall`, as you can guess, is the key here. The "character" Othello is addressing will take a value from his/her stack, assume that value and, afterwards, will output it.

**Length 52 snippet**

```spl
Thou art as pretty as the sum of thyself and my dog!
```

Another sum. Yawn. Assuming this one is addressed to Hamlet, means that `Hamlet = Hamlet + 1`. Or `Hamlet += 1`. Or `Hamlet++`.

**Length 53 snippet**

```spl
Romeo:
 You are as vile as the sum of me and yourself!
```

Ah, yes, something I forgot to mention before: the speaking "characters" can mention themselves on their own lines.

**Length 54 snippet**

```spl
Juliet:
 Is the sum of Romeo and me as good as nothing?
```

Another example of the previous snippet, included in a condition. So what we have here is `if (Romeo + Juliet == 0)`.

**Length 55 snippet**

```spl
Juliet:
 You are as lovely as the sweetest reddest rose.
```

So, here, Juliet is praising the "character" she's speaking to (let's assume it's Romeo, for Shakespeare's sake), declaring that he/she is 4. Yes, another assignation of values.

**Length 56 snippet**

```spl
Othello:
 You lying fatherless useless half-witted coward!
```

Snippet 48 properly done, with a "character". If you're too lazy to scroll up (like I'd be), this means the one being insulted is receiving the value -16.

**Length 57 snippet**

```spl
Romeo:
 If not, let us return to Act I. Recall thy riches!
```

I've already explained how conditions work on SPL on a general basis; however, a more inline analysis is needed. We don't have `else` in here: per instance, in this example, if the condition failed, the program would return to Act I; but if it were true, it would continue to the next instruction, which is a `Recall` - a pop from the stack, that is.

**Length 58 snippet**

```spl
Romeo:
 You are as disgusting as the square root of Juliet!
```

Grabbing snippet 44 and presenting how the instruction should be presented. If this was a dialogue between Romeo and Othello, then we could translate this to Java as `Othello = Math.sqrt(Juliet)`.

**Length 59 snippet**

```spl
Othello:
 You are as vile as the sum of yourself and a toad!
```

OK, if Othello is talking to Romeo, this would be equivalent to `Romeo+(-1)`; `Romeo--`, for short. Pretty basic, right? That's SPL for you.

**Length 60 snippet**

```spl
Is the quotient between the Ghost and me as good as nothing?
```

For short, `if (The Ghost/Hamlet == 0)`, assuming the "me" belongs to Hamlet.

**Length 61 snippet**

```spl
Thou art as handsome as the sum of yourself and my chihuahua!
```

Once you peel away the layers and layers of words and insults, you notice that SPL is pretty much a basic thing, without cool functions and stuff. So we have loads and loads of arithmetic functions on the program's body. So, if this one was addressed to Juliet, it would be equivalent to `Juliet++`.

**Length 62 snippet**

```spl
twice the difference between a mistletoe and a oozing blister!
```

Yes, yes, more arithmetic operations. Roughly, these 62 bytes of SPL can be translated to `2*(1-2*(-1))`. This would be a pretty awesome golfing language, right? Right.

**Length 63 snippet**

```spl
You lying stupid fatherless rotten stinking half-witted coward!
```

Snippet 48 outputted -16, this one is equal to -64: `2*2*2*2*2*2*(-1)`.

**Length 64 snippet**

```spl
your coward sorry little stuffed misused dusty oozing rotten sky
```

From what I understand of SPL, this is perfectly legit. You have a whole lot of insulting adjectives what proceed a "positive" noun. Since adjectives have no special distinction whether they're negative or not (their only value is multiplying the number at their right by two), we can have completely silly sentences like this one. Which is equivalent to 256. Because `2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*1=256`.

**Length 65 snippet**

```spl
You are nothing! You are as vile as the sum of thyself and a pig.
```

Hmm, so much hate, isn't it? So, what we have here is equivalent to `y=0; y=y+(-1);` Probably could have been "golfed" to `You are a pig!`, but heh.

**Length 66 snippet**

```spl
You are as beautiful as the difference between Juliet and thyself.
```

So, subtract Juliet from yourself, heh? This one's pretty simple to decode: `Romeo=Juliet-Romeo;`, assuming it's Romeo who's being spoken to.

**Length 67 snippet**

```spl
Juliet:
 Am I better than you?

Romeo:
 If so, let us proceed to Act V.
```

How most conditions work on SPL. You test the expression and, if it's true (or not: see snippet 33), you jump to another part of the program; otherwise, you'll continue on to the next sentence.

**Length 68 snippet**

```spl
The Ghost:
 You are as small as the sum of yourself and a stone wall!
```

Yes, yes, I'm getting a bit monotonous. But SPL is like that. As I stated a bit earlier, its expressions are a mixture of arithmetic operations. Thus, this is yet another incrementation - since `stone wall` is a neutral "noun".

**Length 69 snippet**

```spl
Thou art as disgusting as the difference between Othello and thyself!
```

Instead of a sum, we have the subtraction between two characters, Othello and whoever is being spoken to.

**Length 70 snippet**

```spl
You are as handsome as the sum of Romeo and his black lazy squirrel!
```

We return to the additions, yes - call me formulaic, heh. We translate this to `Romeo + 2*2*1`.

**Length 71 snippet**

```spl
Scene I: Dialogues.

[Enter Juliet]

Othello:
 Speak your mind!

[Exit Juliet]
```

A Scene can be as small as this. `Juliet` enters the stage, Othello tells her to output her stored value, then she gets off stage again.

**Length 72 snippet**

```spl
twice the difference between a mistletoe and an oozing infected blister!
```

One more arithmetic operation - because SPL is riddled with them. We can translate this to `2*(1-2*2*(-1))`.

**Length 73 snippet**

```spl
You are nothing! Remember me. Recall your unhappy story! Speak your mind!
```

Four instructions in a row?! I'm quite proud of myself, actually. Anyway, let's assume this is a dialogue between Romeo and Juliet (and he's speaking): this means that Juliet's value starts at 0; then, Juliet will push Romeo's value into her stack of memory, pop it and output it in its entered form. Simple, right?

**Length 74 snippet**

```spl
You are as sweet as the sum of the sum of Romeo and his horse and his cat!
```

Yeah, yeah, boring example, I know. But this is `X = (Romeo + 1) + 1`.

**Length 75 snippet**

```spl
Is the remainder of the quotient between Othello and me as good as nothing?
```

Well, this is pretty straightforward. If your decoding skills are malfunctioning, it translates to `if (Othello % X == 0)`.

**Length 76 snippet**

```spl
Thou art as rich as the sum of thyself and my dog! Let us return to scene I.
```

The jump from snippet 26 with an expression before it. A `goto` on SPL isn't always found near a condition, it can be like this - and, of course, this type of `goto` will always be found at the end of an Act or Scene, since instructions after it will never be compiled/performed. The first instruction is pretty simple: `x=x+1`.

**Length 77 snippet**

```spl
[Exit Hamlet]

[Enter Romeo]

Juliet:
 Open your heart.

[Exit Juliet]

[Enter Hamlet]
```

So, we have Juliet and Hamlet on stage; but we're in need of the value from Romeo. Thus, in order to spare the compiler from a very nasty headache, firstly we remove Hamlet from the stage (though it could have been Juliet the one to go), we tell Romeo to get on stage, Juliet gives him an instruction to output a number (see snippet 21's explanation), then Romeo gets out of the stage and Hamlet returns. Pretty straightforward and simple.

**Length 78 snippet**

```spl
The Ghost:
 Speak thy mind.

Lady Macbeth:
 Listen to thy heart! Remember thyself.
```

So, The Ghost (Hamlet's deceased father) is telling Lady Macbeth to output her value, while she orders The Ghost to read a number and push it into his stack.

Comment: This incredibly interesting and your profile picture is a perfect fit, he looks precisely like what I imagine an SPL programmer would look like.

Comment: @overactor I don't know whether to be insulted or proud to be likened to a Gumby. ^_^

Comment: Which number system did you use for the calculation `2*2*(-1) = -6`?

Comment: @Nobody A system only I know, apparently... (yes, it was an error, meanwhile corrected)

Comment: Bizarrely this is NOT the most obscure to read example here... and seems to be tied for "least practical".

Comment: @H.R.Rambler "Least practical", you say? Wait until I begin with arithmetic operations (if I get more 100 upvotes, of course)...

Comment: ROFL here's +1 to help you on the way - Once more unto the breach Rodolfo!

Comment: Wish I could upvote more than once... This is interesting stuff.

Comment: @RodolfoDias You can begin. I'm waiting to see them. You have 120 up-votes.

Comment: Only 6239986 votes to go for a [quine](https://bitbucket.org/FlorianPommerening/splquine).

Comment: Can we have more snippets?

Comment: Does SE seriously has support for SPL code highlighting? Does anyone use this programming language in reality? Or they did it for fun?

Comment: "Not better" should be `<=`, not `<`.

Comment: +1 for `my little pony`.

Answer (score 180):

## [Piet](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html)

**Factoid**

Piet is a programming language where the source code consists of images. Program flow starts with the top-left pixel and moves around the image between pixels and pixel groups until it terminates.

For legibility, Piet programs are commonly displayed in an enlarged version. In such a case the term `codel` is used to describe a group of same-coloured pixels that correspond to an individual pixel in the source image.

For this challenge, since Piet does not use characters, one codel per vote will be used for sample programs.

**1 Codel**

[image: 1 Codel]

This is a valid program, it does nothing and terminates. The control flow starts in the top-left (only) pixel and has no way out, which ends the program.

The pixel can in this case be any colour for the exact same effect.

**2 Codels**

[image: 2 Codels]

This will continually read characters from stdin and keep a running total of their unicode values (though nothing is done with this total and it is not displayed).

Progam flow moves back and forth between the 2 codels, since the only way out of each one is into the other. Commands in piet are executed by movement from one codel or region into another, depending on the difference in hue and lightness of the 2 regions. The `input` is the command moving left-to-right and then the `add` is right-to-left. On the first `add` command, nothing will happen since there is only one value on the stack, and the specification says that commands without enough values available are ignored.

This program is a loop that will never end, as most piet programs will be at extremely small sizes, since it takes at least a few codels to properly "trap" the program flow and end it.

**3 Codels**

[image: 3 Codels]

This is a basic echo-type program, it will read a character at a time from stdin and print it to stdout.

Again this is an infinite loop. The program starts by travelling left-to right, which does the `input` then `output`. The program will continue to flow in the same direction whenever it can. At the light green codel the only exit is to start moving back the other way. When travelling back right-to-left it attempts to perform `subtract` and `add` commands, but the stack is empty so these become no-ops.

**4 Codels**

[image: 4 Codels]

Prints out 2 to stdout indefinitely.

Not a particularly interesting program functionally, but now that we finally have a composite number of codels we can show off slightly more advanced flow than left-to-right. When program flow attempts to exit a codel it first tries the current direction. If it's unable (in this case due to the edge of the image) it rotates 90 degrees clockwise and attempts to exit again. In this case, the program goes around clockwise 1 codel at a time, `push`ing 1 onto the stack twice, `add`ing the ones together, then `output`ing the result.

**5 Codels**

[image: 5 Codels]

Repeatedly reads a character at a time from stdin and tracks the sum of their unicode values.

This is essentially the same functionality as the 2-codel version, but this challenge is about showcasing the language, and one of the cool things about piet is how you can have different-looking pictures that do the same thing.

Here we see the white codel for the first time, which allows program flow to slide across it without executing instructions. The magenta and blue codels do all the work here. Travelling from blue to red does nothing because it crosses the white codel in the middle. The 2 red ones just `push` the number 1 onto the stack and `pop` it back off as it travels left-to-right then right-to-left across them, and then across the white codel so no instruction is executed.

**6 Codels**

[image: 6 Codels]

Again, repeating earlier functionality with a different look. This is another echo program that reads a character at a time from stdin to stdout.

Here we see our first black codel. Program flow cannot enter a black codel, so from the light magenta codel in the top-right the program will fail to exit right due to the image edge, fail to exit down due to the black codel, and bounce back left into the red codel. The blue and green codels are purely decorative, the program will never enter them.

**7 Codels**

[image: 7 Codels]

Yet another echo program with a different look.

Here we see our first codel blocks larger than size 1. In piet, any contiguous block of codels of the same colour is treated as a single block. The size of the block does not matter except when executing the `push` instruction, so this program is treated exactly like the 3-codel version, except with different colours.

**8 Codels**

[image: 8 Codels]

Reads a number from stdin and outputs the square to stdout, repeatedly.

Control flow is a basic clockwise pattern just as in the 4-codel program. Starting from the top-left, the operations in order are `input`, `duplicate` (pushes an extra copy of the top value of the stack onto the stack), `multiply`, `output`. Then it `push`es the value 1 onto the stack, slides across the white so no command is executed, and then `pop`s that 1 off of the stack when moving from the lower-left to upper-left codel. This returns it to the beginning of the program with an empty stack, and it repeats.

**9 Codels**

[image: 9 Codels]

Adds 1 + 2 = 3, and then terminates.

Now that we have a program with greater than 2 codels in both dimensions, we can finally set up a region that will trap the program and end it instead of looping forever. The first operation moving from the red codel to the dark red region is a `push` of 1, then the program rotates and flows down into the light red codel in the middle and `push`es a value of 2. Flowing from the light red to the light yellow executes an `add` operation. The bottom light yellow bar causes the program to end since there is no way for it to flow out as all the corners are blocked off.

---

The 1- and 2-high programs are quickly becoming ugly and uninteresting so from this point on I'm going to focus on numbers that allow at least a few codels in each direction.

**12 Codels**

[image: 12 Codels]

Finally a program that does something that could be argued as useful (though it's still a bit of a stretch). Reads 2 numbers from stdin sequentially and then outputs their sum, and does this repeatedly.

Program flows left-to-right across the 4 coloured bars perfoming 2 `inputs` followed by an `add` command. It then moves into the lower-right codel and performs an `output`, and then goes left across the white region back to the start.

This could have been done in 8 codels, but since we have the extra space we can make something that's a little bit inspired by an old no-signal TV display.

**15 Codels**

[image: 15 Codels]

Reads a number from stdin and outputs its' square.

This uses a couple of tricks to get a bit of a symmetrical look to a program that actually does something. The leftmost red bar is a different colour on the bottom codel than the rest, taking advantage of the fact that (for me at least) these 2 shades of red look very similar. the program will move from the lighter red region right into the light blue codel, and then straight across the middle of the program to the light green on the right side where it is trapped. It performs `input`, `duplicate`, `multiply`, and `output` operations.

The darker red codel, along with the medium green codels on the top and bottom of the middle column, are decorative and the program will never reach them.

**20 Codels**

[image: 20 Codels]

Reads numbers from stdin until a 0 is read, at which point it outputs the sum of all entered numbers and exits.

We finally have enough room to do control flow in the form of the `pointer` operation. The 4 codels along the top perform `input`, `duplicate`, and `not` operations, and then another `not` operation moving from the magenta in the top-right to the 2-codel yellow below it. The `not` operation pops the top value off of the stack and pushes a 1 if the top value was a 0, and a 1 otherwise. Therefore a double-`not` replaces any nonzero value with a 1. Moving from the yellow bar down to the dark blue performs a `pointer` operation, which pops the top value off of the stack and moves the direction pointer clockwise that many times.

If the top value is a 1 (i.e. we didn't enter a zero) the direction pointer will point left, moving to the magenta codels for an `add` operation (which will be ignored the first time due to only one value on the stack) and then through the white back to the start of the program.

If the top value of the stack is a zero at the pointer operation, the direction pointer will not change and the program will continue downwards. Moving into the lighter blue band will `pop` the 0 that was entered off of the stack, leaving only the sum of the accumulated numbers. Moving into the cyan bar on the bottom will `output` that sum, and then end since the program flow is trapped.

**25 Codels**

[image: 25 Codels]

Countdown! Reads a number from stdin, and then prints a countdown to 1 to stdout one number at a time. For example, if 5 is read, will print 54321.

The first operation from cyan to yellow is the `input`. Then the yellow is where the program "loop" starts. Yellow > Magenta > Blue is a `duplicate` then an `output`, so it prints the top value on the stack but keeps a copy. Moving down the right side, we `push` the value 1 onto the stack then perform a `subtraction`, decreasing our entered value by 1. Next is `duplicate`, `not`, and another `not` moving from the light magenta in the bottom-right to the dark yellow beside it. This is the same zero/nonzero check as the previous program. Moving left into the light blue codel performs a `pointer` operation, that will either move left into the dark cyan to end the program if we're done, or up to the yellow to re-start our loop without the initial input but the original value decreased by 1.

All 3 of the red codels are decorative and could be any colour.

**30 Codels**

[image: 30 Codels]

Fibonacci generator. Prints out terms of the Fibonacci sequence to stdout and doesn't stop.

This is the first introduction of the `roll` operator, as well as the first time that a region size bigger than 1 is used with the `push` operator to get a specific value onto the stack.

As always starts in the top-left moving right. The first 2 operations `push` a 1 onto the stack and then `output` it since the Fibonacci sequence starts with two 1s, but the main program loop will only print 1 once. Then it `push`es 2 more 1s onto the stack to end up in the dark magenta in the top-right to start the main program loop.

Moving down the right side we `duplicate` and `output` to print off the next term of the sequence, then `duplicate` again to get a copy of the current sequence value. Moving left across the bottom executes 2 `push` operations. Since the light red region in the bottom-right is 3 codels in size, the first `push` will push a 3 onto the stack instead of a 1.

Moving up into the light blue is a `roll` operation. This pops the top 2 values off of the stack and performs a number of rolls equal to the first value popped, to a depth equal to the second value popped. In this case, it will perform 1 roll to a depth of 3. A roll to depth `n` takes the top value of the stack (our duplicated current value) and buries it `n` places deep. Our stack is only 3 deep right now so it will bury the top value at the bottom.

Moving up once more performs an `add` operation adding together the current sequence value with the previous sequence value. Our stack now has the next (new current) sequence value on top, and the last value below it. The program now moves right across the white into the dark magenta to start the loop again.

The yellow pattern in the middle is never used.

**54 Codels**

[image: 54 Codels]

Prints "hi!" to stdout

Not a particularly long message, but printing in piet takes a surprising amount of room. Printing is done by using unicode values, and integers are pushed onto the stack by using the size of the region that is being exited. Since we have a very limited number of codels for this challenge, we use some math to get up to the printable range we want.

The program starts with a `push` of 5 from the cyan region on the left. From here, it flows right along the top with 6 `duplicate` operations to prime the stack with a bunch of 5s. Next is `push` 1, `subtract` to put a 4 on top of the stack, then 2 `multiply` operations to put 4*5*5=100 on top of the stack. Then a `duplicate` for 2 100s.

Now the program bounces off of the black and starts working leftwards along the bottom. `Push` operations of 3 and 2 and then a `roll` to bury the 2 100s under a 5. Next is `push` 1, subtract, and add to get 100+5-1=104 on top of the stack, which is unicode "h". Next 2 operations are `push` 1 and `pointer` to get around the corner and start moving right along the middle, and then `output` to print "h".

Next is `add` 100+5=105 on top of the stack, and `output` to print "i". The stack now contains two 5s. `Push` 1, `add`, `multiply` gives (1+5)*5=30. Finally `push` 3 and `add` for 33, and `output` for the trailing "!". The program then goes right through the remaining white space to end in the green on the right.

Comment: Hah yes, was waiting for this :)

Comment: How's that any different from a 2D character language? It's just the way you convey the cell values.

Comment: @jdlugosz Many esoteric programming languages, when you get down to it, are just a few basic stack manipulation commands with a unique way of encoding the commands. I personally think encoding them in an image is a neat idea.

Comment: If we're talking functional equivalence, you could ask "How's that any different from a Turing machine?" but then you could level that same question at a cat, or the planet Jupiter, or any of the other languages...

Comment: Could you explain what each codel in each image does individually? This is harder to understand than ><>.

Comment: @mbomb007 I've updated the descriptions on most of the programs to add more detail, hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: The 9 codel example looks like a mini-pokeball. Nice.

Answer (score 154):

## [><> (Fish)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish)

*(Note: Some snippets build on previous snippets, so unlike most answers I've decided to put them from earliest to latest.)*

**Factoid:**

Like Befunge, ><> is a stack-based 2D language. This means that instructions aren't executed linearly like most traditional languages — program flow can be up, down, left or right!

**Length 1 snippet:**

```
X
```

`X` is an invalid command in ><>, so the error message `something smells fishy...` is printed. In fact, this is the only error message in ><>, whether the cause be division by zero or trying to pop an empty stack.

**Length 2 snippet:**

```
1n
```

Program flow in ><> starts from the top left and is initially rightward. `1` pushes a 1 onto the stack, then `n` prints it as a number (as opposed to as an ASCII char). But ><> programs are toroidal, meaning that the instruction pointer wraps around when it reaches the end of a line. So after the `n` we wrap to beginning, push a 1, print, wrap to the beginning, push a 1, print ... and we end up printing `1`s forever!

**Length 3 snippet:**

```
"o;
```

Here `"` is string parsing, `o` outputs as an ASCII char and `;` terminates the program. But what does the program actually do as a whole?

Well first we start string parsing, pushing every char we see onto the stack until we find a closing `"`. We push an `o`, then a `;` ... and wrap the instruction pointer back to the start. But now we're on a `"` so we *stop* string parsing, and finally we execute the `o` and `;` as normal to print the top of the stack (the `;`) and terminate.

Yes, we've just used the same quote char to start and end a string!

**Length 4 snippet:**

```
42n;
```

Based on what we've seen so far, you might expect this to push 42, output as a number then terminate. But all instructions in ><> are single chars, so this actually pushes **a 4 and a 2**, then outputs the top of the stack as a number (only the 2) and terminates.

**Length 5 snippet:**

```
<v
;>
```

Remember, ><> is a 2D language. This means that there's got to be ways to change the direction of program flow!

Like Befunge, one way you can do this is via the arrows `>^v<`. To illustrate how they work, let's look at the above program:

- Program flow is initially rightward
- `<` makes program flow leftward — we go off the left and wrap around to the `v`
- `v` makes program flow downward — we go down to the `>`
- `>` makes program flow rightward — we go off the right and wrap around to the `;`
- Finally, we terminate.

**Length 6 snippet:**

```
";"00p
```

Another cool feature of ><> is that it's reflexive — the program can modify its own source code on the fly!

Here we push a `;`, followed by two zeroes. `p` then pops the top three elements `y`, `x`, `v` (`y` being the top of the stack) and places `v` at the position `x,y`. In other words, the `p` in this program puts a semicolon at the position `0,0`, turning the code into `;;"00p`. This then allows the program to terminate, as the instruction pointer now wraps around and executes the newly-placed `;`.

**Length 7 snippet:**

```
\7*n;
6
```

*Un*like Befunge, ><> also has mirrors (`\/|_#`) which reflect the direction of program flow. So here we:

- Start rightward, but the `\` reflects us downward
- Push a 6 and wrap
- Hit the backside of the `\` and reflect back to rightward
- Push a 7
- Multiply the top two of the stack
- Output and terminate

Moving horizontally through a `_` mirror or vertically through a `|` mirror is a no-op.

**Length 8 snippet:**

```
"r00g>o<
```

Quite possibly the simplest ><> quine if an error is allowed to be thrown. The two new instructions here are:

- `r`: Reverse the stack
- `g`: Get — pop `y`,`x` and push the character at `x,y` onto the stack (counterpart to `p`)

Using the string wrapping trick from before, the program initially pushes `r00g>o<` then hits the first quote again. The stack is then reversed, giving `<o>g00r`. After that we push the char at `0,0`, the `"`, to give `<o>g00r"`. Finally, we trap an `o` between two arrows, outputting the top of the stack until there's nothing left and we get an error.

**Length 9 snippet:**

```
x0\>
\1n>
```

`x` (lower case) moves the instruction pointer in a random direction, and the program showcases this functionality by printing random bits forever. Try following the arrows and mirrors to figure out how this works! (Don't forget to check all four directions, including up and left)

**Length 10 snippet:**

```
;a comment
```

There's no comment syntax in ><> — it doesn't need one. Just write what you want anywhere and make sure it doesn't get executed as code!

**Length 11 snippet:**

```
1!X2!X+!Xn;
```

`!` is a trampoline which skips over instructions. It's particularly useful when used with `?`, a *conditional* trampoline which pops the top of the stack and executes the next instruction if the popped element is nonzero. We'll see how this works later.

The above code prints 3 by skipping over the `X`s, only executing `1! 2! +! n;`.

**Length 12 snippet:**

```
01v
ao>:@+:n
```

Prints the Fibonacci numbers forever starting from the second `1`, one on each line. The new commands are:

- `a`: Push 10, which we need for newline. `a-f` push 10 to 15 respectively.
- `:`: Duplicate top of stack
- `@`: Rotate the top three elements of the stack, e.g. `[5 4 3 2 1] -> [5 4 1 3 2]`.

Trace for the first few iterations:

[image]

**Length 13 snippet:**

```
i:d=?v
l?!;o>
```

A "tac" program which reads in a line of input and outputs it reversed. Thanks to @tomsmeding for the snippet.

`=` pops the top two elements and pushes 1 if they're equal, 0 otherwise. The first line keeps reading in input until ASCII char 13 (carriage return) is found, at which point it moves to the second line.

The `l?!;o` loop is an important construct in ><> which outputs the entire stack. Unlike `>o<`, it doesn't cause any errors. This is how it works:

- `l` pushes the length of the stack
- We check the length with `?`:

  - If the length was nonzero, then the next instruction `!` is executed, skipping the `;`
  - If the length *was* zero, then we don't execute `!` and terminate due to the `;`

Note that no output actually happens until you hit carriage return.

**Length 14 snippet:**

```
32.

   X67*n;
```

In addition to changing the direction of program flow, you can actually move the instruction pointer anywhere you like!

`.` pops `y`,`x` and teleports the instruction pointer to `x,y`, maintaining direction. Note, however, that you need to move to one square before where you want to go — the instruction pointer is updated before the next instruction is executed. So here the instruction pointer lands on the invalid `X`, but all is okay since the pointer moves to the `6` before continuing execution.

`.` makes it possible to convert most ><> programs into a one-liner, but why would you want to lose the fun of 2D? :)

**Length 15 snippet:**

```
01+:aa*=?;:nao!
```

Prints the numbers `0` to `99`, one on each line. This program demonstrates a neat use of the `!` trampoline — to ensure that the initial 0 is only pushed once.

**Length 16 snippet:**

```
"r00g!;oooooooo|
```

A proper quine which *doesn't* throw errors, inspired by the quine on the [esolang page](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish).

If you wondered about how to modify the previous quine (snippet #8) so that it wouldn't cause an error and thought "why don't I just add a ton of `o` instructions?", then you might realise that for every `o` you add, you need to output another `o`! This quine neatly solves the problem by putting a `|` mirror at the end, which allows each `o` to be used **twice**.

If we switch to single quotes (which are also for string parsing), then an alternative quine which doesn't use `g` is

```
'r3d*!;oooooooo|
```

**Length 17 snippet:**

```
b2,63,.

   17,n;
```

We have addition (`+`), subtraction (`-`), multiplication (`*`), modulo (`%`)... but what about division? It's there, but since `/` is already a mirror, division has been assigned the `,` symbol instead. Interestingly, division is *float* division, not integer division!

The above program explores some undefined behaviour by trying to jump to `11/2, 6/3`. The [Python intepreter](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6392418) seems okay if the first coordinate is not an integer (although it jumps to the wrong spot), but chokes if the second isn't.

**Length 18 snippet:**

```
123456${{$}nnnnnn;
```

We've seen `r` which reverses the stack and `@` which rotates the top three elements. Here are a few more commands which move elements on the stack:

- `$`: Swap the top two elements
- `{`: Shift the whole stack left
- `}`: Shift the whole stack right

To show how this works, here's the program trace:

```
123456 ------> 123465 ------> 234651 ------> 346512 ------> 346521 ------> 134652
       $ Swap        { L shift      { L shift       $ Swap        } R shift
```

Then we output, giving `256431`.

**Length 19 snippet:**

```
"reward"4[roooo]oo;
```

Up until now I've been saying "the stack", "the stack"...

Although most programs use only one stack, ><> can actually have multiple stacks! Here are the relevant instructions:

- `[`: Pops `x` and moves the top `x` elements to a new stack
- `]`: Removes the current stack, and moves its values to the underlying stack.

Here's the trace for the above program:

```
       [r e w a r d]       Push "reward"
4[     [r e] [w a r d]     Move four elements to a new stack
r      [r e] [d r a w]     Reverse the current stack
oooo   [r e] []            Output "ward"
]      [r e]               Remove the current stack, no values to move
oo     []                  Output "er", giving "warder" altogether
```

Note that simply pushing `reward` and then outputting it again with `oooooo` would print `drawer`, due to the "first in, last out" nature of stacks.

**Length 20 snippet:**

```
aa*5+\
7a*2+\
oo;  \
```

A little known feature of ><> is that, like Python, backslashes can be used for line continuation in many cases.*

The above code is functionally the same as

```
aa*5+7a*2+oo;
```

<sup>*Disclaimer: The reason why this works may or may not be for a completely different reason</sup>

**Length 22 snippet:**

```
1&fv ;n&<
&1->:0=?^:&*
```

In addition to stacks, ><> also has registers (one for each stack) which can be used to store values. Calling `&` for the first time moves the top value of the stack to the register, and executing `&` again moves the value back. This can be very useful when accumulating a value, for example sums and factorials.

The program above calculates the factorial of `f` (15), printing 1307674368000. Here's the trace for `f` replaced with `4`:

[image]

**Length 24 snippet:**

```
"Hello, World!"rl?!;of0.
```

We have enough chars for everybody's favourite program! Here we use the `.` teleporter for the output loop.

**Length 25 snippet:**

```
0i:0(?v$a*$"0"-+!
   ;n~<
```

Unfortunately ><> only allows reading from STDIN one char at a time, which makes reading in numbers a little tricky. For input consisting of digits 0-9, this program is essentially atoi, converting a string of digits from STDIN into a number on the stack (which is then printed).

Another note is that on EOF, `i` pushes -1 onto the stack. This makes checking for EOF easy by comparing to 0 using `(`, or "less than".

This snippet also uses `~`, which pops and discards the top element of the stack.

**Length 33 snippet:**

```
i>:nao:1=?;\
 ^  ,2v?%2:/
 ^+1*3<
```

Up until now, most snippets have either been relatively linear, or were just simple examples demonstrating ><>'s functionality. Now I can give an example which highlights how easy it is to visualise program flow in ><> with a well-laid-out program.

The program reads in a single ASCII character and runs the `3x+1` algorithm on its code point (In ><>, characters are basically integers). Each step of the algorithm is printed until we hit 1.

Here is a trace for the first few iterations with input `a` (code point 97):

[image]

**Length 44 snippet:**

```
a&>i:0(?v"+"$\
/&^?=0l< "a*"/
\:1+&2p/\0
n
;
```

I don't feel like I've done the `p` command justice, having only used it once all the way back in snippet #6, so here's a different atoi function. What's cool about this one? The program *writes the expression needed to calculate the number* as it reads the input!

So for input like `573`, after all chars are read the end of the third line will look like `\0a*5+a*7+a*3+`, which evaluates to 573!

Once again, the input is expected to be digits only. [Trace GIF here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gAn3.gif).

**Length 74 snippet:**

```
>i:'A'(?v:'N'(?v:'['(?v\
  :'a'(?v:'n'(?v:'{'(?v\
^      o<    +d<  -d-d<o
```

If you've managed to get down to here, then you might agree with me when I say that this is one very readable ROT13 program. Given a char `c1`, we find the first char `c2` in `AN[an{`, such that `c1 < c2`, then apply the appropriate offset by adding/subtracting `d` (13). Note that `[` and `{` are the chars directly after `Z` and `z` respectively.

Try it in the console, and watch the letters transform as you type!

<sup>(You can also pipe in the input, but as I'm missing the EOF check `:0(?;` it'll stop with an error when it tries to print -1 as a char)</sup>

Comment: An idea for the 13 snippet: `i:d=?v NEWLINE o;!?l<` -- prints input line backwards

Comment: I wish I could give this more up votes, I am now inspired to begin learning ><>...

Comment: +1 for starting at top and going down (and also just because it's fun to read).

Comment: @mbomb007 it's a shame, though, that the order can't go left/right and wrap to the bottom of the page :P

Comment: Your length 8 snippet would be a true quine if you wrote `something smells fishy...` on the next line.

Answer (score 153):

## C – [edit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/44698/edit)

Thanks for the votes! When compared to other languages and what they can do in limited bytes, C looks obsolete, fussy and too dependent on the developer. In many ways it is: scripted and higher level languages with automatic memory management are much more expressive and quicker to production than C will ever be.

So why feature C?

The hidden secret behind all those scripting languages is that the interpreters are likely written in C (or more recently, C++ or Java). The first C++ compilers actually compiled to C code. In fact, until there's a market for a direct compiler, it's usually more cost effective to write a compiler to generate C, and then compile that.

If you're working on very small platforms, maybe even without an operating system available, you're likely working in C. These days, just about every appliance has a microcontroller embedded in it, no doubt programmed in C. When they need it small and fast, C is the way to go. (Also FORTH, for the masochists.)

Knowing C takes you as close to the metal as you can go without getting into assembler, and helps you in other languages. You have a good idea how a C++ virtual function probably works. You know when you write those pass-by-value recursive functions in PHP, that internally it's doing a lot of memory allocation and copying, so you instinctively try out pass-by-reference. Callbacks and references don't freak out C developers, maybe Haskell does though.

As Kernighan and Ritchie mentioned in their preface of the classic *C Programming Language*, 2nd edition, *C is not a big language, and it is not well served by a big book.* I'm trying to follow this advice: examples do double, triple or more duty if possible.

All the snippets are at least compilable on their own. Those that are linkable and executable are indicated as such. I know this isn't a requirement, but it makes it simpler than trying to explain the framework required to make any code snippet work.

I also tried to make sure each code snippet was as short as possible so that I'm not introducing extra spaces just to pad to a certain length. In cases where code is indented, the indents are not included in the length, just one character for each new line.

**Factoid**

C rocks.

**Length 0 snippet**

World's shortest self-reproducing program http://www.ioccc.org/1994/smr.hint

**Length 1 snippet**

```c
;
```

C makes a distinction between compiling and linking. Many entities in C are just compiled and linked later - an example are all the static and dynamic libraries.

Other entities are just included and generate no code by themselves.

The above semi-colon will certainly compile into object code, and do nothing!

**Length 2 snippet**

```c
x;
```

C, being an older programming language, has gone through several iterations. The earliest in widespread use was developed by Kernighan and Ritchie and abbreviated K&R. K&R C is notable for making a lot of assumptions about your code if you don't explicitly provide them.

In particular, in K&R C, the code above is assumed to be a global integer `x` initialized to 0. Compiling it in K&R mode will produce an object file which provides any program linking to it this variable for its use.

**Length 3 snippet**

```c
??/
```

C is so widespread that it needs to provide compatibility features for systems which do not have all the characters it uses. The above is a trigraph for the backslash, which is used in C as a line continuation character. The above will compile, likely with a warning that there isn't a line following.

A common culture in C is to ignore compilation warnings, and many large code bases invariably have a few or more warnings when they're being built.

**Length 4 snippet**

```c
f();
```

Again with K&R, the above is "filled out" to mean upon compilation that "There exists, with global linkage, a function `f`, to be provided later, which takes a fixed but unspecified number of arguments and returns an integer."

Note the fundamental differences between this and `f;`.

**Length 5 snippet**

```c
s="";
```

K&R C is notable for being truly forgiving. Upon compilation, this code will provide an integer `s` for global linkage which is initialized to the starting address of an empty string (I think). K&R quietly handles all the coercions, including truncation if an integer isn't large enough to hold the address.

It is constructs like these which have generated many difficult-to-find bugs and provided much inspiration in IOCCC competitions.

**Length 6 snippet**

```c
o=042;
```

A gotcha of even old timers, a leading 0 in a literal number means the digits following are in the octal base. The above code, upon compilation, will provide an integer `o` for global linkage initialized to decimal 34.

This feature of C has bitten many developers striving to pad their numbers to make them line up nice and even!

**Length 7 snippet**

```c
f(){f;}
```

The above code is a function with a body. But what does it do? It retrieves the address of the function, and does nothing with it! Typically what the function will return is undefined. Nonsensical code like this can often compile without warning.

**Length 8 snippet**

```c
main(){}
```

This represent the shortest compilable and linkable code in C. While in modern versions of C, functions usually cannot be defined implicitly, for historical reasons this restriction is relaxed for `main`.

This marvel of a program, which does nothing but return 0, will compile to non-negligible size, and link in various C runtime routines. You can compile and link with verbosity set to full to see what is going on under the hood.

**Length 9 snippet**

```c
#define Z
```

A mainstay of C header files is the `#define` preprocessor directive. C programs compile in various stages, and in one of these stages these definitions are substituted with their actual values.

When an argument is missing, C will imply `1`, so the above would substitute `1` wherever `Z` is used in the source code.

The above would typically be put into a header file and `#include`d as required.

**Length 10 snippet**

```c
enum{P,Q};
```

The `enum` keyword provides a sometimes type-safe way to define a series of constants. Like defines, they are often used in header files. The above code when included would define `P` as an integer of 0 and `Q` of 1.

**Length 11 snippet**

```c
volatile v;
```

The `volatile` keyword is to let the compiler know that a variable may be changed by other agents and not to make assumptions that it will remain constant between accesses.

**Length 12 snippet**

```c
#pragma once
```

`#pragma once` is a non-standard but widely supported preprocessor directive to indicate that the current source file be included only once in a single compilation.

The traditional and fully supported technique is to use `#include` guards with the disadvantages of added code and possible name clashes.

**Length 13 snippet**

```c
w(){for(;;);}
```

There are numerous conventions in C, and one of these is how to represent infinite loops. In this case, `for(;;)` indicates no initialization, no exit check which defaults to 1 meaning true - i.e. don't break, and no looping code.

Sometime it's possible to do everything inside of the `()` and the loop itself needs no body. In this case a dummy semicolon is added at the end.

In the code above, when compiled, it will provide a function which will enter a tight busy loop - one of the no-no's in software design - and never return.

**Length 14 snippet**

```c
int a[]={1,2};
```

Arrays in C do not need the lengths specified. The empty square brackets `[]` tell the compiler to "figure it out yourself". However in C, unlike other languages, there isn't a built-in way to prevent accessing an array outside of these bounds, leading to the "shoot yourself in the foot" metaphor that C is known for.

The code above, when compiled, will provide a global mutable array `a` of two integers initialized with 1 and 2.

**Length 15 snippet**

```c
const long k=7;
```

The `const` specifer is a later addition to C borrowed from C++. A common interview question is "Does it make sense to define a variable as `volatile const`?". `const` along with `enum` and `inline` are intended to reduce the reliance on `#define` which has issues with type safety.

**Length 16 snippet**

```c
extern void **q;
```

`extern` is used to indicate that a variable is declared elsewhere. The `void *` type is the standard generic type in C, meaning it doesn't need to be explicitly cast to or cast from in assignment statements. The `**` operator sequence means pointer to a pointer, which often blows the minds of newbies, but is perfectly valid and often used C.

**Length 17 snippet**

```c
double d=4/3-1/3;
```

If you were to print the above, the result would be one, and you'd think, super! Change to `double d=4/3-2/3;` and what's the answer? It's still one! C is using integer arithmetic to calculate 4/3 → 1 and 2/3 → 0, and 1 - 0 → 1!

**Length 18 snippet**

```c
main(){puts("!");}
```

Finally we get to some code that actually does something! `puts` is a favorite of C golfers because it doesn't require a header file to use.

`puts` will also add a line feed to the output. Conversely, its counterpart `gets` will strip line feeds. One should never use `gets` except in very controlled circumstances - it has no protection for buffer overruns and is the root cause of many exploits.

**Length 19 snippet**

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
```

The inclusion of header files is often a personal signature of developers. Many include `lib` and `io` regardless if they are needed. Some order the header files so the lengths are increasing or decreasing. Most put `<>` before `""`. Personally I have used this signature in my TA days to check for cheating among students: same header signature? take a closer look!

**Length 20 snippet**

```c
char*p=(char*)0x300;
```

C is designed to be used on very low level rudimentary platforms. In some cases you might need to access special memory mapped ports directly.

In the code above the address of a port is defined as hexadecimal 300. You would access the value of the port by using `*p`, as in `*p=0xff;` to turn all bits on, or `v=*p;` to retrieve the current value.

**Length 21 snippet**

```c
int w=sizeof(double);
```

The `sizeof` operator provides the size in bytes of a type. With variable names the brackets aren't required e.g. `double d;int w=sizeof d;`.

**Length 22 snippet**

```c
asm("xorl %ecx,%ecx");
```

How `asm` is to be used is defined by the compiler. The above is an example of Linux gcc in-line code on an Intel platform.

The original Unix had a small but non-negligible fraction of its code in assembler. Even today, if speed is of primary concern and portability absolutely isn't, you'll see it used.

On compatible systems, the code above will compile, and it will be literally an isolated assembly instruction with no conventional means of accessing it! BTW `xor R,R` is a common assembly language idiom for clearing a register quickly.

**Length 23 snippet**

```c
union u{char c;int i;};
```

A `union` will provide at least enough space for the largest element. You might see it used in conjunction with `void *` to provide a common "opaque" type in certain libraries. In this case, the union will usually be part of larger structure, with the structure having a field to identify the union type.

**Length 24 snippet**

```c
/*INTS*/int i,j,k;//INTS
```

The original C comment was delimited as `/* comment */`, and borrowed the `// comment to end of line` format from C++.

**Length 25 snippet**

```c
int main(void){return 1;}
```

This is the more compliant version of the length 8 snippet above. The return type and function types are specified, and it has an explicitly returned value.

The convention in C is to use a return value of `0` for success and `1` for failure, or if you want to be strictly conformant `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` as defined in `stdlib.h`.

**Length 26 snippet**

```c
typedef struct{int x,y;}P;
```

`typedef` is extremely useful, in particular, `typedef struct`. In modern terms you might call it "object-orientation-light".

After including the above, the code can use `P` as a regular type in declarations and functions, with full type-checking. Unlike C++ though, you can't define operators like +,*, or <<, hence "object-orientation-light".

**Length 27 snippet**

```c
#define C(x,y)(((x)+1)*(y))
```

C has a convenient macro `#define` syntax.

A common newbie error is to omit inner and/or outer brackets, resulting in hard-to-find operator precedence errors.

**Length 28 snippet**

```c
struct f{int s:1,e:8,m:23;};
```

C can explicitly define bit-fields which can be assigned and read and manipulated like any integer.

The above is an approximation of an IEEE single-width floating point data structure.

**Length 36 snippet**

```c
f(unsigned x){return!!x&!(x&(x-1));}
```

In many languages, you don't need to care about how numbers are represented. In C, you need to be intimately aware of their internal representation.

The best example of this I can think of is determining if an integer is a power of two {1, 2, 4, 8, ...}. Those not familiar with C will do loops and shifts and all manner of stuff for O(log(n)) run-time, not bad, but above is a function which will do the same in O(1) run-time. I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to confirm it works, but it really does...

The `!!` convention is often used to coerce an integer from non-zero and zero to 1 and 0 respectively. Many C developers like to use these kinds of tricks (often at odds of those who value code clarity).

Super keen C developers can confirm that the above will work on ones-complement and signed hardware. For those wondering, you're almost certain to be working on twos-complement hardware right now. Only the really lucky (or unlucky depending on your perspective) need to worry about this!

**Length 48 snippet**

```c
#include<complex.h>
double complex c=3.0+I*4.0;
```

C99 includes support for complex numbers. As you can see from the code, it takes the form of a modifier for a real type. You could also use `int complex c=3+I*4;` but internally it coerces to a floating point type. The above code will compile in gcc using `gcc -std=c99 -c length-48.c`.

If you want to see more of the internals, try compiling with the -E switch. For my version of gcc, the declaration above becomes `double _Complex c=3.0+(__extension__ 1.0iF)*4.0;`. Note that the complex type is a significant addition to the language, not just a few cheap macros.

This is just a teaser, when we get to more than 125 characters, then we can start having some real fun with complex numbers!

**Length 51 snippet**

```c
#include <math.h>
main(){double d=sqrt(sin(3.2));}
```

For various reasons, C doesn't automatically link to the standard mathematical functions such as sin, cos, tan, sqrt, etc. So if they're used, but not linked, the developer will be presented with the linker error **undefined reference to 'sqrt'**, or some other error.

In gcc, the code above will compile and link using `gcc length-51.c -lm`.

Note `sin(3.2)` will return a negative number, of which the square root is not legal in the real domain. In C, a special value `NaN` is returned to indicate this error, which the program is free to ignore!

In C99, there are a lot of new exception handling functions to provide very safe and fine-grained control of these kinds of math errors, which just about nobody uses!

**Length 63 snippet**

```c
static int w;static int X(int x){static int s=0;s^=x;return s;}
```

Or formatted more sanely:

```c
static int w;
static int X(int x)
{
    static int s=7;
    s^=x;
    return s;
}
```

As you might have guessed, this is all about the keyword `static` which has more than one meaning in C.

In the first two cases, `static` is telling the compiler that integer `w` and function `X` are not visible outside of this file or compilation unit, i.e. they are internal.

These functions are not intended to be called externally, so they might not check the arguments for validity, and cut other corners. Because they have internal scope, you can redefine `w` and `X` in other files, and they will usually be separate.

In the last case, `static` indicates that the integer `s` retains its value between function calls. The first time `X` is called, `s` will be its initial value `7`, when it is exclusive-ORed with `x`, the new value will be retained.

Internally, although it is implementation dependent, the usual memory organization is that `s` is residing on the heap, specifically initialized memory, while the argument `x` is residing on the stack. Where variables reside is important if you want to implement recursive algorithms, for example.

A gotcha in C are clashes with global variables. Until `w` and `X` are actually defined as `static`, if they are defined globally somewhere, then `w` and `X` will refer to the global entities instead.

Here `q` and `w` may not be initialized to the same value, because a global `w` is being used to set `q`:

```c
static int q = w;
static int w;
```

If a global `w` doesn't exist, the compilation should fail.

Here `q` and `w` will be initialized to the same value:

```c
static int w;
static int q = w;
```

Typically, designers will reduce name clashes by adding a distinctive prefix or suffix to their global variables and functions.

In C99, `static` has gained another use, e.g. `int Y(int a[static 10]);` which means that there is a function `Y` which takes an array of *at least* 10 integers.

**Length 74 snippet**

```c
void f(register int*p,register int*q,register int l){while(l--)*p++=*q++;}
```

Or laid out nicely:

```c
void f(register int *p, register int *q, register int l)
{
    while (l--)
        *p++ = *q++;
}
```

The keyword `register` provides a hint to the compiler that using hardware registers would be beneficial here. The above function will copy `l` integers from `q` to `p`, using hardware registers if possible.

Sometimes the speedups could be significant. For example, in the 68K microprocessor family, the line `*p++ = *q++` could be translated to a single instruction `MOVE.W (Ap)+,(Aq)+` vs. six or eight if you didn't use `register`. The 68K microprocessor had explicit post-increment and pre-decrement modes, so the savvy developer, if he knew the platform, would tailor code by using `x++` and `--y` vs. `++x` and `y--`.

These days compilers mostly ignore `register`, other than not allowing addresses to be taken of them (e.g. in the above `&l` would cause a compiler error).

**Length 88 snippet**

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int f(int x){return(x>1)?x*f(x-1):1;}int main(){printf("%d\n",f(12));}
```

Or with a saner layout:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int x)
{
    return (x > 1)? x * f(x - 1): 1;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", f(12));
}
```

Ah, recursion! The snippet is a complete program to compile, link and run. The function `f` calculates the factorial of its argument `x` by using the recursive formula f(x) = x * f(x - 1). Factorials get big really quickly, so for example `f(12)` is the largest value you can get in a signed 32-bit integer.

For an example of **really** recursive code, look into naïve implementations of the [Ackermann function](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#C).

Smart compilers can optimize the function, using the hint `inline` and "unroll" the function when constants are provided as arguments so that:

```c
f(12)
```

Becomes:

```c
12 * 11 * 10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

Without any function calls required!

Other compilers can reorganize the function:

```c
int f(int x)
{
    return (x < 2)? 1: f(x - 1);
}
```

And implement something called tail-recursion. This in effect replaces the last function call to a simple goto and lets that function deal with the return. The benefit is less stack thrashing, faster and smaller code.

In assembly language, these kinds of optimizing opportunities are really easy to spot and can be implemented by something called a "keyhole optimizer", which basically looks for small patterns and replaces them with something faster and/or smaller.

**Length 117 snippet**

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int c,char**v){int a,b;sscanf(v[1],"%d%*[\t ,]%d",&a,&b);printf("%d\t%d\n",a,b);return 0;}
```

Or:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int c, char **v)
{
    int a, b;

    sscanf(v[1], "%d%*[\t ,]%d", &a, &b);
    printf("%d\t%d\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

C borrowed from languages contemporary at the time, the concept of a universal I/O which could be consistently applied to any device, whether console, punch card, tape, disc or printer, but in true C form, it allowed the developer to create very terse but powerful statements.

In the above snippet, it will take command line input, parse two integers separated by spaces, tabs or commas and output them. It takes advantage of a newer `scanf` specifier `%*[\t ,]` which will: `[\t ,]` pull out all tabs, spaces and commas, and: `*` ignore them.

I remember revising some C++ code where the developer was doing everything the "pure" C++ way with `<<` and an arsenal of methods like `find` and `substr`. It was at least a dozen lines and it still couldn't handle commas as delimiters. I replaced all that clunky code with a single `sscanf` line like above!

**Length 132 snippet**

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int c,char**v){while(--c){++v;printf("|%s|\n|%5s|\n|%-5s|\n|%.5s|\n|%5.5s|\n",*v,*v,*v,*v,*v);}return 0;}
```

Or:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int c, char **v)
{
    while (--c)
    {
        ++v;
        printf("|%s|\n|%5s|\n|%-5s|\n|%.5s|\n|%5.5s|\n", *v, *v, *v, *v, *v);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The functions `printf`, `sprintf`, `fprintf` etc. use format specifiers to define the width and padding of the output.

Compile and run the above using command line arguments to see the various outputs:

```c
> main xyz 123456
|xyz|                                                                                                                                                
|  xyz|                                                                                                                                              
|xyz  |                                                                                                                                              
|xyz|                                                                                                                                                
|  xyz|                                                                                                                                 
|123456|                                                                                                                                             
|123456|                                                                                                                                             
|123456|                                                                                                                                             
|12345|                                                                                                                                              
|12345|
```

Note the `.5` limits the output for the specifier to at *most* five characters, while the leading `5` ensures the output is at *least* five characters, with `-` indicating left alignment. Combining them sets the output at exactly five characters.

Comment: I don't think that there was a requirement to add a new factoid for each upvote :)

Comment: @Optimizer - Until I can get into some actual compile-and-link code, I'll add an explanation for those more familiar with scripting languages.

Comment: That can take a whiiile

Comment: _A common culture in C is to ignore compilation warnings_, I don't think this is anywhere near the truth!

Comment: If you have a large project and consider multiple compilers, it can be quite futile to try to eliminate all warnings.

Comment: Wrt #7, gcc will not automatically return 0; usually you get some garbage value.

Comment: "A common newbie error is to omit the second group of brackets, resulting in hard-to-find operator precedence errors."

It might be worth noting that your example still does not have enough brackets. You've protected against things like 2*C(2,2) but not things like C(2+0,2).

Comment: @user19057 - thanks for catching that, corrected.

Comment: @feersum - after confirmation, #7 revised, thank you.

Comment: suggestion: do something with the "complex" datatype

Comment: Thank you. Just letting what I wrote pass public opinion before I continue. Also looking at the C99 exception handling which almost everyone ignores!

Comment: For #8 : the shortest compilable and linkable program is actually `main;`, which however crashes at runtime.

Comment: #18 puts is a macro defined in stdio.h  fputs deosn't require a header.

Comment: @Quentin - I wonder if you can set it to an op-code for RETN, e.g. main=195; for Intel x86, and have it return without error? It's still one character more than main(){}!

Comment: @Jasen - I guess it depends on distribution. In `gcc`, no macros in `<stdio.h>`. Too many problems with macros, in particular address of to use in callbacks.

Comment: As a developer who began with C myself (before moving to Python, and not counting Visual Basic), I can confirm that Haskell freaks me out.

Comment: Can we talk about code snippet 0. Which points to a copyrighted quine that has no code it in. Does that mean they copyrighted null???

Comment: @DisplayName101 - haha - he should be claiming payment on the infinite copies everyone has of this program!

Comment: @Kik Am I the only one who thought of Mr Burns when I saw that comment?

Comment: I'm a C programmer, and I'm not scared of Haskell.

Comment: FYI: OOP has nothing to do with operator overloading, a language can be object oriented without it.

Comment: So what about `volatile const`? I can guess a useful interpretation that it might have, but I don't know if it is correct.

Comment: @ChristianSievers - Can be used for a read-only hardware register — `const` prevents writing to it, which in some cases might have unintended effects, while `volatile` ensures no optimizations are done with respect to accessing it.

Answer (score 148):

## x86 Machine Code

#### Factoid:

x86 Machine Code is the assembled version of x86 Assembly that the processor actually runs. It was developed back when memory and storage space were expensive, and was designed to be somewhat backwards compatible all the way to the Intel 8008. Keeping executable code small was one of the goals, and it utilizes variable length instructions and a [CISC architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_instruction_set_computing) to help achieve this (which has had the drawback of making it more complicated to improve performance on modern processors). This, along with the bare-bones nature of assembly and machine code in general, gives x86 programs the ability to be extremely compact.

#### Length 1:

Now for the first program:

```
0xC3
```

Open up a hex editor, enter that byte, and save it as test.com.

You now have valid MS-DOS program which immediately returns without doing anything, since 0xC3 is the instruction 'RET'. This does however show another interesting aspect for golfing with x86: the .com file format. This executable format has absolutely no header - the file is simply loaded into memory starting at address 0x100, and then execution is started at 0x100. This means no bytes wasted on metadata!

#### Length 2:

Our next program:

```
0x4D 0x5A
```

or 'MZ' in ASCII.

Ok, I cheated a bit, that really isn't a useful program, since it corresponds to the instructions

```
DEC     BP
POP     DX
```

Which aren't actually useful for starting a .com program. In fact, that's the whole point of those two values - no reasonable .com file should start with them! .com files were limited to 65280 bytes in size (64KiB - 0x100), so when larger programs started to be needed, a new format had to be developed. This was the .exe file format, which does have a header. However, MS-DOS needed to keep the .com extension on certain components for backwards compatibility, so it needed a way to detect whether a .com file was really an .exe. They chose the sting 'MZ' as this magic number, and to this day, if you open up a Windows .exe (or .dll) file in a hex editor, you'll see they start with those two bytes. It amuses me that even the most modern Windows program starts with a compatibility constraint from the 70's.

#### Length 3:

Now for an infinite loop:

```
41 E2 FD
```

Which translates to

```
start:
inc cx
loop start
```

This program increments the value of CX (which will be >0 to begin with), then executes the loop instruction. Loop is an excellent example of a CISC instruction since it combines 3 simple operations into one special-purpose operation: it decrements the value of CX, checks if it is 0, and jumps to the target label if not. There are also forms of loop that check other flags in addition to ending when CX is 0. We could have done just 'jump start' for a 2 byte infinite loop, but this was more interesting.

#### Length 4:

A program that is minimally useful:

```
40 CD 10 C3
```

Translated to assembly:

```
inc ax    ; 1 byte
int 10h   ; 2 bytes
ret       ; 1 byte
```

This program sets the console to 40x25 characters, clears the screen, then returns to the command line. AX is set to the video mode we want (1), then the BIOS interrupt 10h is called to actually set the video mode & clear the window, before returning. Expect to see more of these BIOS interrupts in the future.

#### Length 5:

We can now implement a pause program:

```
B4 01 CD 21 C3
```

Translated to assembly:

```
mov ah,1  ; 2 bytes
int 21h   ; 2 bytes
ret       ; 1 byte
```

This program tells the BIOS to wait for a key to be pressed and echos it to the screen before returning. This also demonstrates how on the x86, some of the registers can be partially read or written. In this case, we set the top byte of AX (AH) to 1. On 32 bit processors, you can also operate on the low 16 bits without affecting the top 16 bits. This ability to modify partial registers can be handy for assembly programmers, but has drawbacks for modern processors trying to perform [out-of-order execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution), since
they can introduce false data dependencies.

#### Length 9:

Now to actually display output:

```
68 00 B7 07 AB 40 79 FC C3
```

Translated to assembly:

```
; These two instructions set up ES, the 'extra segment'
push 0xb700 ; 3 bytes
pop  es     ; 1 byte
label:
stosw       ; 1 byte, Store Word - Copy AX to [ES:DI] then add 2 to DI
inc  ax     ; 1 byte
jns  label  ; 2 bytes, Jump Not Signed - Jump unless the sign flag is set (when inc AX yields 0x8000
ret         ; 1 byte
```

The output is the default character set repeated in different colors. The low byte of AX is the character code, and the high byte specifies the colors to use.
[image: Default character set repeated in different colors]

16 bit programs could only address up to 64KiB directly. To get around this, the x86 used 'segments' - special registers that would be multiplied by 16 and added to all memory accesses to give 20 bits of addressable memory. A program could change the values of these segment registers in order to access more memory - or special areas of memory: this program modifies the extra segment in order to write to video memory.
Different types of memory access used different segment registers, allowing code, data, and the stack to be accessible in different chunks of memory at the same time. The default segment could also be overridden for many instructions.

#### Length 20:

Let's make something recognizable - we will use 'Rule 90' to draw Sierpinski triangles.

```
B0 13 CD 10 68 0F A0 1F AC 31 C2 88 94 3E 01 87 D3 93 EB F4
```

In assembly:

```
mov al,13h      ; 2b
int 10h         ; 2b - Set the video mode to 13h

push    0xA00F  ; 3b
pop     ds      ; 1b - Set the data segment to video memory

start:          ; This loop runs 'Rule 90' to draw Sierpinski triangles
lodsb           ; 1b - load al with [ds:si] then increment si

xor     dx,ax   ; 2b - xor the left and right values of the previous row of pixels
mov     [si+318],dl ;4b - store result to memory

xchg    dx,bx   ; 2b - swap register values
xchg    ax,bx   ; 1b - swapping with ax is 1 byte shorter

jmp     start   ; 2b - infinite loop
```

Sample output:
[image: Sierpinski Triangles]

For this program, we use the somewhat famous 'Mode 13' - a graphics mode that has a resolution of 320x200 with 256 colors. It was used by [many popular DOS games](http://www.classicdosgames.com/video/vga13.html), such as Doom.

#### Length 21

Let's see who manufactured the CPU we're running on.

```
0F A2 66 60 BB EE FF B9 0C 00 8A 17 43 B4 02 CD 21 E2 F7 FF E1
```

Translated to assembly:

```
cpuid         ; 2b  CPU ID - retrieve processor information based on the value in AX. For AX=0,
              ;     the 12 bytes in EBX, ECX, and EDX are loaded with a vendor identification string
pushad        ; 2b  Push all registers on the stack (32 bit version)
mov  bx,0xffee; 3b  Start of the vendor identification string on the stack
mov  cx,12    ; 3b  12 characters to print
print:    
mov  dl,[bx]  ; 2b  Character to print
inc  bx       ; 1b  Advance string position
mov  ah,2     ; 2b  Set AH to the 'Print character to STDOUT' value
int  21h      ; 2b  Call the bios interrupt to print
loop print    ; 2b  Decrement CX and jump if it is not zero
jmp  cx       ; 2b  Instead of restoring the stack, just jump right to the exit point
```

Sample output:

```
c:\misc>cpuid.com
GenuineIntel
```

This program uses the CPUID instruction to get info about the processor it is running on, in particular, the vendor identification string. Most people will see 'GenuineIntel' or 'AuthenticAMD', unless they have an uncommon CPU manufacturer or are running in certain virtual machines.

#### Length 26

We can now do interesting animations

```
B0 13 CD 10 C4 07 BB 40 01 59 99 89 F8 F7 F3 31 D0 AA E2 F6 26 FE 05 47 EB FA
```

In Assembly

```
mov al,13h     ;2b
int 10h        ;2b Enter Video Mode 13h

les ax,[bx]    ;2b Set ES to (roughtly) video memory
mov     bx,320 ;3b Set up  BX asdivisor
pop     cx     ;1b Zeroize CX

start:
cwd            ;1b Sign extend AX to DX, AX will never have the sign bit set so this zeroizes DX in 1 byte
mov     ax,di  ;2b Copy video memory pointer
div     bx     ;2b Divide by width to get AX = Y pos, DX = X pos
xor     ax,dx  ;2b X pos ^ Y pos
stosb          ;1b Store and increment video pointer
loop    start  ;2b CX starts at 0, so this will loop until it wraps around

cycle:
inc     byte [es:di];3b Increment value in video memory to animate
inc     di     ;1b Increment video memory pointer
jmp     cycle  ;2b Infinite loop
```

And the output will look like this:

[image: Marching XOR]

The function X pos ^ Y pos produces an interesting fractal, especially when animated

#### Length 27

Not only can you generate text and graphics in a small x86 .com program, you can also generate sound and music:

```
BA 31 03 B0 3F EE BA 30 03 B0 93 EE B4 01 CD 21 3C 1B EE 3C 1B B0 7F EE 75 EC C3
```

In assembly:

```
    mov dx,0x331            ; value for the midi control port
    mov al,0x3F             ; command value to set midi mode to UART
    out dx,al               ; output the command to the midi control port
play_loop:
    mov dx,0x330            ; value for the midi data port
    mov al,0x93             ; midi instrument value (piano)
    out dx,al               ; output to midi data port
    mov ah,1
    int 0x21                ; read character from stdin, with echo
    cmp al,27               ; test if it is escape
    out dx,al               ; output the ascii value as the midi note to play
    mov al,0x7F             ; note duration
    out dx,al               ; output note duration
    jne play_loop           ; loop if escape was not pressed
    ret
```

This program uses the midi card to turn the keyboard into a piano. To do this, the midi card is set to UART mode, which plays midi notes as soon as they are received. Next, the program waits for a character to be pressed, and outputs the ASCII value as a note to the midi card. The program runs until escape is pressed.

#### Length 29

Let's use an [iterated function system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system) to generate a Dragon Curve fractal:

```
B0 13 CD 10 89 D0 01 CA 29 C1 D1 FA D1 F9 73 03 83 E9 7A B4 01 CD 16 B8 02 0C 74 E6 C3
```

Translated to assembly:

```
mov  al,13h
start:
int  0x10    ; This does double duty, setting the video mode to 13h at program start,
             ; and calling the 'draw pixel at coordinates' interrupt when looping
mov  ax,dx   ; The next couple instructions are our IFS, the algorithm is aproximately
add  dx,cx   ; f(y) = 0.5x + 0.5y
sub  cx,ax   ; f(x) = 0.5x - 0.5y OR f(x) = 0.5x - 0.5y - 1
sar  dx,1    ;
sar  cx,1    ;
jnc  skip    ; This jump handles pseudo-randomly switching between the two functions for x,
             ; based on if the previous value of x was odd or not.
sub  cx,122  ; Magic number, chosen since it provides sufficent 'randomness' for a filled in
             ; fractal and a good scale to the fractal. 102 and 130 also work.
skip:
mov  ah,1
int  0x16    ; Get keyboard state, zero flag will be set if no key has been pressed
mov  ax,0xC02; Set up AH for the draw pixel function when int 0x10 is executed,
             ; AL = color, CX = column, DX = row
jz   start   ; Loop if a key hasn't been pressed
ret
```

Output:

[image: Dragon Curve]

Pressing a non-control key will cause the program to exit. This is based off of  [Fire Coral](http://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=64484) by Desire on Pouet.net.

#### Length 52

This program is a bit of a double feature, it shows a bit of the x87 floating-point co-processor, and self-modifying code.

```
B3 07 D9 E8 B1 11 DE 0E 32 01 E2 FA BE 0A 24 56 B1 09 DF 34 AC D4 10 
86 E0 05 30 30 50 E2 F5 44 B4 2E 50 89 E2 B4 09 CD 21 FE 06 03 01 4B
75 D2 CD 20 0A 00
```

When run, the program will output several mathematical constants:

```
1.00000000000000000
3.32192809488736235
1.44269504088896341
3.14159265358979324
0.30102999566398120
0.69314718055994531
0.00000000000000000
```

These are One, Log2(10), Log2(e), Pi, Log10(2), Log e(2), and Zero.

In assembly:

org 100h

```
mov     bl,7         ;Counter for the total number of constants to print
start:
fld1                 ;Floating point constant to load on the FP stack,
                     ;start with 1 since it's op-code is the lowest

mov     cl,17        ;Multiply the constant by 10, 17 times to get the
mult:                ;printing part as an integer
fimul   word[ten]
loop    mult

mov     si,10+'$'*256;ASCII new line (10) and the end-of-string ($)
                     ;characters. These are used both as
push    si           ;a constant memory location, and stored to the
                     ;stack to format and printing

mov     cl,9         ;print 18 digits (9 pairs)
fbstp   [si]         ;store the integer part of the floating point
                     ;number on top of the FP stack as a packed
                     ;binary-coded decimal number (1 digit/nibble),
                     ;and then pop the number off the FP stack

convert:
lodsb                ;load a pair of packed digits

db 0xd4,16 ; AAM 16  ;ASCII Adjust For Multiply instruction using
                     ;non-standard base 16. This puts AL/16 in AH,
                     ;and AL%16 in AL, unpacking the digit pair.

xchg    ah,al        ;Swap the digit order
add     ax,'00'      ;Convert the digits to ASCII values
push    ax           ;Store digits on the stack
loop    convert

inc     sp           ;AX now holds the 1st 2 digits to print,
mov     ah,'.'       ;so to insert a decimal point, the 2nd digit
push    ax           ;is replaced with a '.', the stack pointer
                     ;is adjusted to overwrite 1 byte, and then
                     ;AX is pushed on the stack

mov     dx,sp        ;Load DX with the start of the print string
mov     ah,9         ;Load AH with the 'Print String' constant
int     21h          ;Call the 'Print String' interrupt to display
                     ;the constant

inc     byte[start+1];Self-modifying code - increment the load
                     ;floating point constant op-code to iterate
                     ;through all of them

dec     bx
jnz     start        ;Exit when all 7 constants have been printed
int     20h


ten: dw  10
```

Floating point math on x86 systems was originally handled by the optional x87 co-processor, it wasn't until the 486 that it was moved onto the same chip. The x87 also had a rather different architecture, it was stack-based, with 8 80bit registers available. It also had a variety of rounding modes, precision, and maskable exceptions that could be set.

This program prints the values for seven constants baked into the processors. It may seem odd that instruction space would be wasted on simple constants like 0 and 1, but keep in mind that the instruction set was created when memory was small, and these instructions are typically 2 bytes smaller than equivalent operations. The program also uses an obscure instruction, FBSTP -'Store BCD Integer and Pop'. Back when the x86 was developed, operations on [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) numbers were more common, and the x86/x87 has several instructions specifically to simplify BCD math, such as the AAM 'ASCII Adjust for Multiple' instruction also used in the program.

In the unprotected memory model used by early x86 programs, there is no distinction between data and code. Because of this, it is easy to iterate through the sequentially encoded 'Load Constant' instructions by simply incrementing the appropriate value.

#### Length 64

Cross-posting my entry for the [Mandelbrot Challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3105/generate-a-mandelbrot-fractal), a program can be written that displays a 320x200 color Mandelbrot fractal in only 64 bytes.

```
B0 13 CD 10 C4 07 99 89 F8 B9 40 01 F7 F1 83 E8 64 FE CE 31 DB 31 F6 
89 F5 0F AF F3 01 F6 0F AF DB 70 19 0F AF ED 70 14 01 EB 70 10 29 EB
29 EB C1 FB 06 01 D3 C1 FE 06 01 C6 E2 DB 91 AA EB C6
```

In assembly:

```
mov al,13h ; set up graphics mode 13
int 10h

les ax,[bx]; trick to set video memory

FillLoop:
cwd
mov ax,di  ; di is the current position on screen
mov cx,320 ; convert di int x,y screen coordinates
div cx     ; CX is the iteration counter, exit the loop if it hits
           ; zero before the value escapes.
sub ax,100 ; center the fractal vertically
dec dh     ; center the fractal horizontally

xor bx,bx
xor si,si

MandelLoop: ; Fairly standard Mandelbrot routine,
mov bp,si   ; exits if the values overflow
imul si,bx
add si,si
imul bx,bx
jo MandelBreak
imul bp,bp
jo MandelBreak
add bx,bp
jo MandelBreak
sub bx,bp
sub bx,bp

sar bx,6   ; We use fixed point math with the lowest 6
add bx,dx  ; bits being the fractional portion, so this
sar si,6   ; rescales the values after multiplication
add si,ax

loop MandelLoop

MandelBreak:
xchg ax,cx ; Write the escape itteraction as the color
stosb
jmp FillLoop
```

The end result is this image:

[image: Mandelbrot Fractal]

This program uses fixed-point math to generate the fractal, since it takes fewer bytes. The lowest 6 bits of the 16 bit registers is considered to be the fractional part of the number, and the values are rescaled after being multiplied.

Comment: Of all of the languages to see on PPCG, I did not expect this.

Comment: Wow.

Plus other characters to make this a comment. But seriously. Wow.

Comment: this takes me back a ways! Too bad I can no longer hand-edit .com files in 64-bit Windows 8 :\

Comment: @Michael Edenfield That's what DOSBox is for!

Comment: 20 byte Sierpinski is very impressive.

Comment: I consider myself to be a good programmer, but when I look at this I must admit defeat.

Comment: Wow, it is very interesting about `MZ`!

Comment: Where can I learn it ?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Try the [sizecoding wiki](http://www.sizecoding.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Comment: Heh thx I'll check it out. Welcome back to SE (ig you were not on SE). XD

Answer (score 123):

## Haskell

You might want to read from the bottom up. Sometimes I refer back to lower snippets, but never to higher ones, so it might help understanding.

Readers who do not know Haskell: am I clear? When am I not clear? I can't tell.

## Length 86 snippet

A foldable instance for our tree data structure (snippet 23).
Foldable is a type class - as in, a class(/group) of types. These are parallel to interfaces in Java. They essentially generalize over types, unifying types which have common characteristics; for example, they can be added together (`Monoid`), containers (`Functor`), can be printed as text (`Show`, which we have met already, in the `show` function), and so on.
This one unifies data types which are list-like in that they can be iterated over or flattened to a list.

In this snippet, we define the instance by defining `foldr`, which essentially iterates over the data type from right to left. Now, we can use a bunch of general pre-written code. First, we define a helper function to get a singleton tree, to avoid all the clutter: `s a = N E a E`. Now:

```
sum (N (s 3) 7 (N E 5 (s 8))     === 23
product (N (s 3) 7 (N E 5 (s 8)) === 840
toList (N (s 3) 7 (N E 5 (s 8))  === [3,7,5,8]
```

and so on.

Here's a picture of our tree:

```
7
| \
3  5
    \
     8
```

## Length 70 snippet

```
primes=sieve[2..] where
 sieve(p:xs)=p:sieve(filter(\x->x`mod`p/=0)xs)
```

This is a prime sieve!

(note: `/=` is what `!=` is in other languages)

This works by defining a function `sieve` which filters the list and keeps only the numbers which are not divisible by any previous prime. It is defined recursively - to `sieve` is defined as to split the list to a first element `p` and a tail, filter from the tail any number divisible by `p`, `sieve` the remaining bit, attach `p` to the start of that, and return.

Again, we are working with infinite lists here - but the computation will halt in time as long as you don't require an infinite amount of primes to be computed.

```
take 4 primes === [2,3,5,7]
```

## Length 68 snippet

Finally, a quine!

```
main=do putStr s;print s where s="main=do putStr s;print s where s="
```

In your first time reading this, you might think that the output of this quine would be missing the quotation marks, and why would you once write `putStr` and once `print`? It sounds the same.

In Haskell, `putStr` is a function that just prints the contents of the string it gets to stdout; `print`, though, prints things to stdout.
So, `print 4` is equivalent to `putStr "4\n"`, but `putStr 4` is nonsensical - `4` is not a string!
So, when `print` gets a value, it first converts it into a string, and then prints that string. Generally the way to convert things to strings is to find the way you would write it down in code. So, the way you would write the string `abc` in a string in Haskell code is `"abc"`, so `print "abc"` actually prints `"abc"`, not `abc`.

<sub>How fortunate I have enough votes now, I won't have to golf these things</sub>

## Length 33 snippet:

```
main=go 0
go n=do print n;go(n+1)
```

The important thing to note is that we didn't use a loop. Haskell doesn't loop. Haskell recurses. Haskell doesn't have loops. It's deeper than that: **Haskell doesn't even have Control flow**.
How, you might ask? Well, it doesn't need any.

On with the details.
This program prints an infinite increasing sequence of integers, starting from 0.
`go` prints them starting with its input, then `main` calls it on `0`.

`do` is a special syntactic power of Haskell. In this scenario, it just combines I/O actions, just like `>>` does (see snippet 22).

## Length 26 snippet:

```
map f=foldr(\x y->f x:y)[]
```

This defines the `map` function, probably familiar to everyone, using `foldr`.
Notice that although we didn't declare `map`'s type, the computer somehow knows its type is `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, i.e. given a function from `a` to `b`, and a list of `a`s, return a list of `b`s.

How did it know?? ;-)

## Length 25 snippet:

```
main=putStr"Hello World"
```

The standard Hello World. Note the types: `main` has type of `IO ()` and `putStr` has type of `String -> IO ()` (a function from strings to I/O actions which return nothing).

## Length 23 snippet:

```
data T a=E|N(T a)a(T a)
```

This is a standard definition of a Tree. How much easier than all those lines required to define a tree in Java, C, or anything else.

(see snippet 10)

Let's break it down:

`data` - this declaration declares a data type.
`T a` - a tree containing elements of type `a`. This is the type we are defining.
`=` - every value of `T a` will be any of the following, separated by a pipe `|`.
`E` - one of the possible values of `T s` - the empty tree.
`N (T a) a (T a)` - the other possible value of a tree - a node. Each node consists of the left child (`(T a)`) the element (`a`) and the right child (`(T a)`).

## Length 22 snippet:

```
main=putStrLn"y">>main
```

A Haskell `yes` function.
`>>` is an operator which combines and sequences two I/O actions. It has type of `>> :: IO a -> IO b -> IO b`.

`main` is defined recursively by itself, as the I/O action which first prints `"y"` and then does whatever `main` itself does.

## Length 18 snippet:

```
fix f=r where r=f r
```

A better definition for `fix`. (See snippet 14.)
The problem with the first definition, `fix f = f(fix f)`, is that every time we call `fix f` `fix` recalls `fix f`, which recalls `fix f`, generating endless copies of the same computation. This version fixes it by defining `r` (result) to be the result; as such, `f r = r`. So, let's define `r = f r`. Now we return `r`.

## Length 17 snippet:

```
f n=product[1..n]
```

This is the functional way to define factorial.

## Length 16 snippet:

```
f n=(\x->x+x+x)n
```

`(\x -> x + x + x)` is a lambda (someone thought `\` resembles the letter.).

`(\x -> x + x + x) n` is the lambda applied to `n` (this is exactly the same as `n + n + n`).

`f` is the multiply-by-three function (also `f = (*3)`)

## Length 15 snippet:

```
sum=foldl (+) 0
```

This defines the `sum` function using a fold. A fold is basically a loop over the elements of a list with one accumulator.
`foldl` takes as arguments some function `f` and some initial value `x` for the accumulator and a list `xs`. The function `f` should get as input the previous accumulator value and the current value of the list, and it returns the next accumulator.
Then the fold iterates on the list values, applying `f` on the previous accumulator, and then returns the last accumulator.

Another way to think about folds is like the fold 'inserts' `f` between the list values and with the initial accumulator in one of the sides. For example, `foldl (*) 1 [4,2,5]` evaluates to `1 * 4 * 2 * 5`.

## Length 14 snippet:

```
fix f=f(fix f)
```

The `y` combinator. It is usually named `fix` because it finds the fixpoint of the equation `f x = x`. Note that `x = infinite loop` can also sometimes a solution, so `fix (\x -> x^2 + 5*x + 7)` won't solve the equation `x^2 + 4*x + 7 = 0` but instead return an infinite loop.

You may also note that not always `x = infinite loop` is a solution, because of Haskell's laziness.

This version is a time and space leak; we will redefine it in a longer snippet.

## Length 13 snippet:

```
f=sum.map(^2)
```

This defines the **function** `f` that given a list returns the sum of its squares. It is the **function** composition of the **function** `sum` and the **function**`map(^2)`, which in turn is the **function** `map` applied to the **function** `(^2)` (the *square* **function**), which is in turn a section of the **function** `^` (sections were introduced at snippet 2, and composition at snippet 3).

As you can see, **functions** are quite important in a **functional** language like Haskell. In fact, it has been said that Haskell is the language with the most standard library **functions** which get **functions** as inputs or return **functions** as outputs (this is commonly known as a [higher-order **function**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).

By the way, technically, every two-or-more argument **function** is a function which returns **functions** as outputs (this is called currying).

## Length 10 snippet:

```
data B=T|F
```

This is a definition of Haskell booleans with different names. The boolean type is named `B`.
 This definition introduces two constructors: true (`T`) and false (`F`).
This code snippet basically tells the compiler that every boolean (`B`) is either true (`T`) or false (`F`), or in other words, `B=T|F`.

In fact, all data types ever can be defined in Haskell, when in other languages the number, references and array data types need special support from the compiler. In practice there is special support in Haskell as it would be very inconvenient otherwise, but for example the `Bool` datatype is defined entirely in language.

## Length 9 snippet:

```
main=main
```

This nonsensical program will define `main` to be main. Because Haskell is lazy, values which would require an infinite loop to evaluate can be used freely if we don't use their actual value. Such values which contain infinite loops, like our `main`, are called "bottoms".

A fun fact is that the GHC Haskell compiler can detect these kinds of infinite loops and throw a catchable (!) exception when it is run.

## Length 8 snippet:

```
f(x:_)=x
```

This defines the function `f` which, given a non-empty list, will return its head.

Patterns in Haskell are like Python's sequence unpacking, but generalized for all types. Patterns can either reject or match a value, and if it matches, can bind variables to values.

The patterns in this snippet are:

- `_`: the pattern which matches anything and binds no variable.
- `x`: the pattern which bind anything and binds it to the variable `x`.
- `:`: this pattern gets to child patterns, that is, one for the head, and one for the tail. If the list is non empty, it matches them with the head and the tail.

Pattern matching is highly generalized. In fact, just defining new data types will automatically introduce patterns for working with them.

## Length 5 snippet:

```
x=2:x
```

Whoa, there's so much to explain on this one.

First of all, Haskell is lazy. This means that subexpressions will be evaluated only when strictly necessary.

**Note:** this code snippet doesn't show assignment, but definition. Haskell doesn't have assignment.

This code snippet defined `x`, an infinite list made up entirely of `2`. Usually in other languages `x` has to be evaluated before `2:x` can ever be evaluated, but in Haskell we can do this.

Haskell infinite lists are sort of a mix of iterators and regular linked lists: they act like both (an iteration over a range will use constant memory, for example).

## Length 4 snippet:

```
2:[]
```

This snippet just encodes the singleton list `[2]`.
`:` is the *Cons* operator in Haskell. In fact, the regular list syntax is just syntactic sugar for the cons operator and the empty list literal. This tightly ties in into the way Haskell deals with Pattern matching and Data types (particularly the concept of constructor).

## Length 3 snippet:

```
f.g
```

In Haskell, `.` stands for function composition. Haskell can be written in a "point-free" style, which is characterized by not naming function arguments and instead using the `.` operator to manipulate data flow.

## Length 2 snippet:

```
1-
```

When this code is wrapped in parentheses (for syntactical reasons) it is called a "section". It is then a function that given some number, "fills up" the empty spot and returns one minus that number. This notion is sometimes useful in a functional language like Haskell, where otherwise a lambda would be needed.

## Length 1 snippet:

```
1
```

In Haskell, `1` can be both an `Int`, `Float`, `Double`, `Word` and so forth. In fact, you can write code to define a version of `1` in any type and use it freely.
this is done too in JavaScript, Python and so forth, but unlike those, it is done with full type safety.

## factoid:

Originally, the Haskell committee intended to call the language "Curry" after Haskell B. Curry's name but decided to change the name to Haskell because some puns might arise. Only later they noticed Haskell's similarity to "Pascal" and "Hassle"!

Comment: i don't know if i should replace the factoid with the fact that Haskell has the most function/operators in it's standard library which generate functions from other functions (and that technically every two or more parameter function is such). should I?

Comment: Show it off in a snippet and add it in the explanation.

Comment: `f=0:1:zipWith(+)f(tail f) -- 25 chars`, a functions that returns a lazy-calculated list of the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: ugh i added a bunch of snippets and then my computer shut down

Comment: @proudhaskeller Saving op. I've never done this personally, but if you have a large edit to do at once, you could perform the edit in an external document with saving, then paste it in when it's complete.

Comment: You should update this! More ideas: a typeclass `instance` for your tree type, polymorphic recursion, `Fix`,  `filterM` powerset, primes, quine?

Comment: @Lynn feel free to add some of your own, and edit the existing ones, I just don't have enough time.

Comment: In the length 38 snippet, you say you define a `foldr`, but where is it defined?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon thanks for reading! yeah, sorry, for some reason the length 86 snipet is actually missing. you would've thought someone would have spotted that earlier... well, I'll try to look into it soon

Comment: Since you asked ("am I clear?"): I couldn't figure out how 14 works - how is it interpreted and what's the execution order? Also, what does `x=infinite loop` mean (does the `fix` call lead to an infinite loop, or does it return an "infinite loop" somehow)? Similarly can't figure out how 18 works or why exactly it's better than 14. (Also, the snippet for 86 is still missing.)

Comment: @proud-haskeller The top (length 86) snippet seems to be missing. I don't see any instance there.

Answer (score 101):

## Java

---

### Length 44 snippet

```java
Object a=System.out.append("Hello, World!");
```

Prints `Hello, World!` to STDOUT.

### Length 43 snippet

```java
float[][][][][]a=new float[5][3][7][2][10];
```

`a` contains 10 arrays which each contain 2 arrays which each contain 7 arrays which each contain 3 arrays which each contain 5 `float`s.

### Length 42 snippet

```java
interface A{static void main(String[]a){}}
```

A complete program. Since everything in an `interface` is inherently `public`, we can omit the word `public` from the main method.

### Length 36 snippet

```java
class A{class B extends A{B.B.B b;}}
```

`A` has an inner class `B`. This means we can declare a variable of type `A.B`.

But `B` is a subclass of `A`, which means it has all of the methods, fields, *and inner classes* of `A`. Thus, we can refer to the type `B.B` as well.

In this code, we take this a step further, and give `B` an instance variable of type `B.B.B`.

The moral: following hot questions on SO can teach you a lot of interesting, if pointless, techniques.

### Length 35 snippet

```java
l.stream().map("a"::equals).count()
```

If `l` is a list of Strings, this tells us how many of them equal `"a"`.

### Length 34 snippet

```java
public static void main(String[]a)
```

Method signature of a program's main method. Just 11 more characters and we can make a complete program!

### Length 33 snippet

```java
enum D {NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST}
```

`NORTH`, `EAST`, `SOUTH`, and `WEST` are all constants of type `D`.

### Length 32 snippet

```java
Files.readAllBytes("hello.txt");
```

Reads an entire file, returning a `byte[]` of the contents.

### Length 31 snippet

```java
new String(new char[]{'h','i'})
```

Equivalent to `"hi"`. Useful if the <kbd>"</kbd> key is broken.

### Length 30 snippet

```java
new JFrame().setVisible(true);
```

Creates a new visible frame, which you can place other components into.

### Length 29 snippet

```java
throws ClassNotFoundException
```

Forces every method which call this to use a `try`-`catch` block, or else to pass the error up the stack. Checked exceptions are one of the most controversial decisions of the Java designers.

### Length 28 snippet

```java
int f(int x){return f(x-1);}
```

This function does not run forever; in fact, on a typical computer it takes less than a second. Thanks, Stack overflow.

### Length 27 snippet

```java
Object a=new String[]{"a"};
```

Creates a new array of strings.

### Length 26 snippet

```java
Object.class.newInstance()
```

Creates a new `Object`.

### Length 25 snippet

```java
((Supplier)()->-~0).get()
```

It's best to avoid hard-coding constants. This is an object-oriented way of getting the value `1` without using any constants other than `0`.

### Length 24 snippet

```java
(Function<Long,?>)x->x+1
```

The successor function.

### Length 23 snippet

```java
l.removeIf(x->x%10==0);
```

If `l` is a list of integers, this removes all values divisible by 10.

### Length 22 snippet

```java
int i=(new int[7])[5];
```

Creates a new array of seven integers, and gets the fifth element.

### Length 21 snippet

```java
Arrays.asList(2L,"a")
```

Creates an ArrayList with these elements.

### Length 20 snippet

```java
System.out.print(s);
```

Prints `s`.

### Length 19 snippet

```java
import java.util.*;
```

Allows concise use of classes like `List`, `Map`, `Scanner`, `Timer`, and `Random`.

### Length 18 snippet

```java
Math.addExact(x,y)
```

Adds two integers `x` and `y`. If overflow occurs, the method throws an exception rather than giving an incorrect answer.

### Length 17 snippet

```java
Double.MIN_NORMAL
```

The smallest positive value of type `double`, where the leading bit of the significand is 0.

### Length 16 snippet

```java
System.in.read()
```

Reads a single character from the console.

### Length 15 snippet

```java
Long.reverse(x)
```

Reverses the bits in the binary representation of `x`.

### Length 14 snippet

```java
int x=050+120;
```

`x` is now 160, since anything starting with `0` is treated as octal.

### Length 13 snippet

```java
private C(){}
```

A private constructor prevents other classes from instantiating it. This pattern is used by the `System` and `Math` classes, among others. A private constructor can also be used to enforce the Singleton Pattern.

### Length 12 snippet

```java
static class
```

Allows the creation of inner classes without an enclosing outer class - a solution to a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690128/how-to-instantiate-non-static-inner-class-within-a-static-method) [faced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058974/static-method-returning-inner-class) [by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672563/inner-class-and-static-method-java) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975134/why-cant-we-have-static-method-in-a-non-static-inner-class) [programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944448/what-exactly-is-the-reason-that-we-cannot-declare-static-methods-in-public-inn?lq=1).

### Length 11 snippet

```java
throw null;
```

It's often necessary to throw a `NullPointerException`, but it's also quite wordy. This is a much simpler alternative.

### Length 10 snippet

```java
int[]a,b[]
```

Defines two variables: `a` and `b`. `a` is of type `int[]` and `b` is of type `int[][]`.

### Length 9 snippet

```java
switch(x)
```

Goes to a place, depending on the value of `x`.

### Length 8 snippet

```java
break a;
```

Breaks out of the block labeled `a`.

### Length 7 snippet

```java
goto x;
```

The `goto` keyword is reserved in C, C++, and Java. If `x` is a label, then this code sends the program to the appropriate label – in C and C++. But it Java, it triggers a mysterious `RuntimeException`. In fact, there is no way at all to use the `goto` keyword in Java.

### Length 6 snippet

```java
\u003b
```

Ends a statement. Java is *weird*.

### Length 5 snippet

```java
a-=-a
```

Doubles `a` by subtracting its negation.

### Length 4 snippet

```java
a&=b
```

Sets the value of `a` to the bitwise and of `a` and `b`.

### Length 3 snippet

```java
...
```

Any number of arguments, consolidated into an array.

### Length 2 snippet

```java
<>
```

Allows the compiler to figure out what generic type you probably mean. Very un-Java-like.

### Length 1 snippet

```java
@
```

Indicates an annotation to allow additional information to be shown about methods and classes.

### Factoid

In Java, infinite loops sometimes cause compiler errors. For example, the loop `while(true);` can not be terminated without exiting the method, so any code after that will trigger an "unreachable statement" error. As @Optimizer pointed out, only some infinite loops will be caught this way.

Comment: In java, infinite loops do not cause compiler error. Its your IDE that detects them and produce an error. Java simply has a concept of Unreachable statements, so if you have something like `while(true);` in your code, anything put after that line will throw a compile error of Unreachable statement. The logic behind detecting such statements is very strict, so it will not recognize all infinite loops by any means

Comment: @Optimizer Well, the infinite loop causes the statement to be unreachable, which causes the compile error, so it's transitively true.

Comment: @Optimizer Yes - hence the word "often"

Comment: Oh, you are right there. But it would be nice to add an explanation to that single line in your code itself.

Comment: You just got down-voted, I guess this means you'll have to remove a snippet! ;) (The downvote was for "Java is weird")

Comment: Semi-colons are awesome!

Comment: This is exactly why I left Java for other people. So much stuff I had no idea it could be done in it...

Comment: @Ypnypn sometimes endless loops create compiling errors, sometimes they "avoid" them: `String x() {while(true);}` 
is valid code.

Comment: It seems that the snippet #36 is recursive and can be extended indefinitely: `class A{class B extends A{B.B.B.B.B.B.B b;}}` still compiles.

Comment: Upvoted to help you make a complete program ;)

Comment: -1 for Java. (I upvoted, I promise)

Comment: ClassCastException is not an exception you usually throw.

Comment: `But it Java, [goto] triggers a mysterious RuntimeException` Wrong. `goto` doesn't even compile.

Comment: @durron597 [Done!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/44695/16)

Comment: It should be noted on snippet 31 that this is not a common solution, as often ' and " are on the same key.

Comment: +1 for the `a-=-a` snippet. It just looks so nice.

Comment: @user8397947 The confusion might be because Eclipse allows you to run programs that don't compile - if the rest of the program is well-formed enough, it just replaces whatever it couldn't compile with `throw new RuntimeException("Unresolved compiler error! blah blah blah, more details here")`

Answer (score 101):

## C#

C# is a fun, crazy mix of features from Java, C, Haskell, SQL, and a ton of other languages, and it provides a lot of really nice features and APIs.  It's also known around here for being pretty verbose, but we'll see what we can do!

I'll ignore the usual required boilerplate (no longer required in C#9.0):

```java
class Program { public static void Main(string[] args) { ... } }
```

**Length 1:**

```java
;
```

Commands are terminated with semicolons in C#! An empty line is perfectly valid syntax.

**Length 5:**

```java
x=5f;
```

When you specify literal numbers in C#, the compiler will assume that they are ints or doubles (based on whether they have a decimal point). If you want to use a literal float, you should specify that by appending 'f' to the number, or it will be cast at runtime, incurring a slight cost.

**Length 7 (bytes):**

```java
s=@"
";
```

If you prefix a string literal with an @ sign, it becomes a "verbatim" string literal. Normal string literals parse escape sequences like '\n' into special characters, but verbatim literals don't, allowing you to use the backslash character without escaping it. They can also include line returns, as shown. That could save you a few bytes in golf, or make your multi-line string literals more readable. Just watch out for indentation being included in the string.

**Length 8:**

```java
()=>x=y;
```

This expression is an anonymous function. It returns an object of type `Action` that can be passed around and also called like a function. Anonymous functions inherit the scope in which they were declared, and they pull any local variables in that scope with them anywhere they go.

**Length 9:**

```java
(a)=>a.p;
```

Here's another anonymous function that uses a parameter and return value. The expression returns an object of type `Func` (the Func itself returns the type of `a.p`. You'll use `Func` a lot to interface with Linq.

**Length 10:**

```java
enm.Any();
```

This is our first introduction to Linq! Linq is a set of extension methods that can be called on any object that is enumerable (implementing the IEnumerable interface) - like `Array` and `List`. IEnumerable employs lazy evaluation: it goes through the collection one item at a time, without knowing about the collection as a whole - it could even be infinite!

That's where `Any` comes in - it returns `true` if the Enumerable contains at least 1 item. Much better than calculating out the whole length.

**Length 11:**

```java
var a=1.5f;
```

The `var` keyword instructs the compiler to automatically determine the type of `a`. `a` in this case will be typed as `Single`. Very handy for code golf, as it's shorter by far than almost any type name, though many dislike using it in production code.

**Length 15:**

```java
yield return 0;
```

Here's a crazy statement you may be less familiar with. You know that objects can be enumerable by inheriting IEnumerable, but did you know that *functions* can be enumerable? Declare a function with a return type of `IEnumerable`, and have it `yield return` as many times as you want. When you get an Enumerator to the function, each call to `GetNext` will have the program execute all the code up to the next `yield return`, return that value, and then pause until you advance it again. You use `yield break` to end the iteration.

**Length 16:**

```java
[Obsolete]int a;
```

This snippet shows an attribute. An attribute is a kind of tag you can stick on any declaration in your code. Some instruct the compiler to do certain things, like this one that emits an Obsolete warning if you call `a`. You can create your own by extending `Attribute`, and you can query them using Reflection (more on that later, perhaps). You can go meta and restrict what kind of declarations an attribute can be used on with the `AttributeUsage` attribute.

**Length 17**

```java
c.Count(t=>t==3);
```

Here's a handy golf method. Given a `Func` that maps an element of the enumerable `c` to `bool`, it returns the number of elements in `c` for which that `Func` returns `true`. Much nicer than writing out a loop.

**Length 18:**

```java
foreach(T t in c);
```

This is a for-each loop. With all this talk of enumerable things, this is a much-needed structure. `foreach` is syntactic sugar that will set up an Enumerator for `c` (which must be enumerable) and iterate through it one element `t` at a time. You can alter or examine each individual element, but altering the collection itself will invalidate the enumerator.

**Length 19**

```java
c.Select(t=>t.a/2);
```

This is your 'map' function, for functional programming fans. Select is a nice concise way to perform some arbitrary conversion (defined by a `Func` passed in) on each element of an enumerable. It returns an IEnumerable that will spit out the "converted" elements when you iterate it.

**Length 21**

```java
Console.Write("Hi!");
```

This line writes some text to stdout, and is probably one of the main reasons C# isn't used for golfing much!

**Length 23**

```java
typeof(T).GetMethods();
```

C# supports a very powerful feature called Reflection. Reflection lets you examine the structure of your code at runtime. For example, this call will return an Array of all methods on the specified type. You can examine those methods, call them, or even modify the values of fields and properties. Attributes (see Length 16) are a good way to tag parts of your code for use with Reflection.

**Length 25**

```java
from t in c select t.a/2;
```

Is that SQL? In C# code? Pretty close. This expression does the same thing as the one at Length 19.

**Length 27**

```java
for(var l;;l=new object());
```

C# is a garbage-collected language, which means that any memory you allocate (using the `new` keyword) can be automatically released as long as no references to it exist. This code will run happily forever even though I never explicitly free the memory created. Garbage collection has costs, though - search the web to learn more.

**Length 29**

```java
var e=Enumerable.Range(0,99);
```

`Enumerable.Range` is a potentially handy golf function. It returns a structure that can be enumerated and will yield each number in the range specified, in order. The second parameter is a count, not an index.

**Length 31**

```java
public int pr{get;private set;}
```

Here, we can show a simple 'property', an OOP feature and another hallmark of C#. If you've ever used Java, you've probably made 'get' and 'set' methods for a field in order to separate their accessibility or run code when it's changed. Well, C# lets you declare that code right on top of the field, and also set separate access modifiers for getting and setting. This particular snippet automatically creates a default getter and setter, but makes the setter private.

**Length 32**

```java
public static void m(this T o){}
```

This snippet shows a C# feature that's nice for API design. By applying the `this` modifier to the first parameter of a static method, that method becomes an "extension" method. Once this is declared, `T.m` can now be called on any object of type T as though it were actually a method of T. This can be used to add new functionality to any existing class, without modifying or even having access to its source code.

**Length 38**

```java
int f(int a,ref int b,out int c){c=0;}
```

This method showcases different types of parameter passing you can have in C#. Unmodified parameters are [passed by value](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/%7Emyers/c++/notes/references.html). Parameters prefixed by `ref` are passed by reference: you can assign a completely new object to them and they will carry it back out of the method. Parameters prefixed by `out` are like additional return values: you are required to assign them a value in the method, and they are carried back out just like ref parameters.

**Length 42**

```java
Console.Write("It is \{DateTime.Now()}.");
```

The new C# 6 standard can save you some characters when you have to output assembled strings, using string interpolation. This feature allows you to write any expression in curly braces inside a string literal, and the string will be automatically assembled with the values of those expressions at runtime.

**Length 48**

```java
IEnumerable f(){for(int a=0;;)yield return a++;}
```

Just enough characters now to do something with an actual purpose! This method uses some of ideas we explored above to create an infinite Enumerable that will simply return the integers, one-by-one, starting with 0. Remember that C# employs lazy evaluation with Enumerables, so an infinite sequence is perfectly valid - you can iterate as much of the sequence as you want, and break out at any time.

**Length 56**

```java
int p{get{return mP;}set{mP=Math.Max(value,0);}};int mP;
```

Here is another example of a 'property' (see snippet 31). Here, I have actually defined different code snippets for `get` and `set` rather than using the automatic ones as before. This example demonstrates how you can use a property to validate the value assigned to a variable - here, the value is not allowed to become less than 0. Other good uses of properties include notifying an event when a value is changed, or rebuilding cached values that might be based on this one.

**Length 65**

```java
int v;public static implicit operator int(Program o){return o.v;}
```

This feature is called an implicit cast. It's sort of like an extension method in that it is static code that operates on a specific class (see snippet 32). However, the implicit cast isn't used by calling it - it's used simply by treating a `Program` object as an integer (e.g. `int i=new Program()`). When you do this, the object will be silently converted into the type you're using it as, based on the code in the implicit cast. Best practice says to only do this when no information is lost as a result of the conversion.

Comment: Lets see what you will be able to do with these characters... ;-)

Comment: I would say that it's closer to java than C, actually

Comment: Noted. I think we almost have enough to do some Linq - coming tonight!

Comment: public static implicit operator int(MyClass o){return o.objVal;} //65. With this code, this line is valid: MyClass o1 = new MyClass(10); int o2 = o1; // o2 is 10 now. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx

Comment: More snippets please

Answer (score 100):

## Python 2

Now starting with the newest for your convenience!
To read through length 30 starting with the earliest first, go to revision history.

If anyone has suggestions, feel free to comment.

### Length 100

We reached 100, hurray! Because of this impressive milestone, I have updated this showcase with a new program.

```python
import re
def f(i):
    w = re.sub('\s', '', i)
    s = re.subn('[\W_]', '', w)
    a = len(s[0])
    print '%d + %d = %d' % (a, s[1], a+s[1])
```

[**Try it Online!**](https://tio.run/##zY5BCsIwFET3OcUnUJLQIOpSyDm6SItEmmBA05AfKZ4@fq14BgdmBuZtJj/rdUnH1uI9L6VC8Wz2AYKM6sSAtIKhcYePixQjCg2CHNWH4Y8lKew4nKcvXzfuiN98kmj307bkElMF0c3QA4WhENCBdBrQHiYNrn@3amg45//1iQ6xIFG1Fw)

Taken from [this old answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44532/34718), which was conveniently 100 bytes.

This program uses regular expressions on the input string to count the number of whitespace characters, then non-whitespace characters. It will then display the counts, and the sum total. This challenge had a source restriction, requiring the programs to have an equal number of whitespace and non-whitespace characters. Running this program with itself as input will print `50 + 50 = 100`.

`re.sub` is the function to replace using a regex. `re.subn` does the same thing, but also returns the number of replacements (in addition to the string after replacement). This program also uses a format string with a tuple of parameters to print in the proper format.

---

**Length 52:**

```python
i=0
while s[i-n:]:print(' '*n+s)[i:n+i];i+=1;i**7**7
```

Taken from my entry in the [Fake Marquee Text](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50142/34718) challenge. `s` and `n` need to be set to a string and an integer ahead of time.

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/pfbKuem1hUWJqaqm7NlWdrav0/09aAqzwjMydVoTg6UzfPKtaqoCgzr0RDXUFdK0@7WDM60ypPOzPWOlPb1tA6U0vLHIj@/wcA)

**Length 43:**

```python
#-*-coding:rot13-*-
cevag h"Una fubg svefg"
```

In Python you are able to encode the source with a specific codec. This shows how the source can be written in Rot13. The general syntax is this: `# -*- coding: <codec-name-goes-here> -*-`.

Here it is translated:

```python
#-*-coding:rot13-*-
print u"Han shot first"
```

The `u` specifies that the following string literal is a Unicode string. This is necessary if you want your strings to also be in Rot13, otherwise every string in the source is easily readable despite the encryption. Alternatively, you could use `.encode("Rot13")` after every string (don't forget to use Rot13 on this, too.) According to [this article](https://breakingcode.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/quickpost-hiding-your-python-source-with-rot13/), some alternate encodings are “base64″, “uuencode”, “zlib”, or “bz2″.

**Length 33:**

```python
import cmath
print cmath.sqrt(-1)
```

This is Python's module for [complex (imaginary) numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number). This prints `1j`, since Python conforms to engineering standards and uses `j` as the imaginary unit, though I prefer `i`, which is more commonly used in mathematics, and using `j` and `k` in addition to `i` for the [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion), but I digress. Read the bug/change order [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue10562) (it won't be changed).

**Length 30:**

```python
f=lambda n:n*f(n-1)if n else 1
```

Now we define our own factorial function using recursion and the ternary if-else! As far as I know, this is as golfed as it gets in Python. It could also be written this way: `f=lambda n:n and f(n-1)*n or 1`, showcasing a couple Python's Boolean operators (and also done in 30 characters.) See the length 15 snippet for information on the `lambda` syntax.

**Length 29:**

```python
import math
math.factorial(7)
```

Finds the factorial of 7, returning `5040`.

**Length 25:**

```python
import math
print math.pi
```

Python's math module provides many useful functions and constants. Here's PI. Returns `3.14159265359`. (In the code above, I counted the newline as a character.)

**Length 24:**

```python
f=lambda y:lambda x:x**y
```

This is an example of a closure. Calling `cube = f(3)` will make a cubic function that can then be called with `print cube(24)`, printing `13824`.

**Length 19:**

```python
print"Hello World!"
```

Finally, enough room to print some basic output! The space is not required here, because quotes and parentheses are also delimiters. This will only work in Python 2, since Python 3 changed the `print` function to be called like any other function. In Python 3, use `print("Hello World!")`. For more information on the print function and difference between Python 2 and 3, see [What's New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html).

**Length 16:**

```python
[x*3 for x in l]
```

Once again, assume `l` is a list or any other iterable object such as a string or generator. This statement is known as a *list comprehension*. It is much shorter than using the standard for loop structure. Here, it returns a list with all the numbers multiplied by 3. ALSO, **strings can be multiplied!** So any string in the list will be added (concatenated to itself) that number of times.

**Length 15:**

```python
import this #:)
```

This is actually a length 11 snippet, but I realized I had forgotten to showcase Python's (awesome) [easter egg](http://www.wefearchange.org/2010/06/import-this-and-zen-of-python.html)! Importing this module prints *The Zen of Python* (See Factoid.) Interesting fact: the module `this.py` was encoded in rot13, which I will hopefully feature later.

**Length 14:**

```python
lambda x:x**.5
```

This defines a square root function using Python's `lambda` syntax for a function literal. Function literals in Python can only contain expressions, not statements. This lambda could be assigned to a variable, passed to a function, or executed in-line with `(lambda x:x**.5)(9)`, which returns `3.0`. Using exponents for a square root is an alternative to importing the `sqrt` function in the `math` module.

**Length 13:**

```python
1 if x else 0
```

This is an example of Python's ternary if operator. This was added in Python 2.5 to discourage coders from manually implementing it with Boolean operations. Here, `1` is return if `x` evaluates to `True`, otherwise `0` is returned.

**Length 12:**

```python
s=input(">")
```

This will print `>` for the prompt text and allow the user to input a value. Python 2 interprets whatever value is entered, so any string needs quotes. Python 3 changed this, so that input entered is not automatically interpreted. To enter input without interpreting it in Python 2, use `raw_input()`. In Python 2, `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`.

**Length 11:**

```python
eval("2e3")
```

`2e3` is scientific notation for the float 2 x 10³. The `eval` function interprets and evaluates any string as an expression. In this case, it has the same result as using the literal `2e3` or `float("2e3")`. It returns `2000.0`.

**Length 10:**

```python
range(013)
```

This function returns a list of integers from `0` to the octal value `013`, which is `11` (exclusive), meaning that the list will be `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`. The function takes up to three parameters similar to the `slice` function we reviewed earlier: `range(start, stop[, step])`. The difference is, with only one parameter the parameter represents the stopping value.

Note that Python 3.x has no equivalent. It's `range` is similar, but is actually the same as Python 2's [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange), returning a generator object instead of a list.

**Length 9:**

```python
a,b = b,a
```

Multiple assignment. This is a simple but elegant feature, allowing you to assign multiple values at the same time. In the snippet provided, it swaps `a` and `b`. What about the order of evaluation, you ask? All the expressions to the right of the assignment operator are evaluated before any of the assignments are made. This beats many languages that require an intermediate assignment to a temporary variable.

**Length 8:**

```python
#comment
```

You know what it is... Wait, you don't? You know, those things that let you type arbitrary text to describe a line of code, making it easier to understand? No? Oh, okay...

**Length 7:**

```python
l[::-1]
```

Again assuming `l` is a list, this will return the list in reverse order. The third argument indicates step size. Since all three arguments can be negative values, a negative step size means iterating in reverse order. The empty first and second arguments show that we're iterating over the entire list.

We're getting to where we can start using some more interesting constructs!

**Length 6:**

```python
l[-6:]
```

This is called a [slice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) operation. If `l` is a list, this will return a new list containing the last six elements of `l` as a list. `-6` represents the starting index (6 from the end), and the colon means to continue until the ending index after it (which we left blank, so to the end.) If our list contained the numbers 1 through 10, this would return `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

**Length 5:**

```python
1<x<5
```

One of Python's awesome features is allowing you to chain comparison operators. In many other languages, this would be typed as `1 < x && x < 5`. It gets even better when you consider multiple comparisons:  `1 < x < y < 5` is perfectly valid!

**Length 4:**

```python
0256
```

An integer with a leading zero is a literal octal value. This is a nice trick for code obfuscation as well. This returns the decimal value `174`. In Python 3.x, the octal value would be written as `0o256`.

**Length 3:**

```python
`3`
```

Surrounding an expression in backticks is the same as using `repr()`, which returns the string representation of an object. The function attempts to return the string in such a way that when it is passed as an argument to the `eval` function, it will return the original object. It is *not* the same as using `str()`, though the results are sometimes the same. For this input, `'3'` is returned in both cases. This is a favorite of mine for code golf!

*Works in Python 2 only!*

**Length 2:**

```python
[]
```

An empty list.

**Length 1:**

```python
_
```

The underscore character is a much-used throwaway variable name. If you are using a Python shell (interactive interpreter), however, it holds the result of the last executed statement (and would return it again.) Also, according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/underscore-in-python/5893946#5893946), it is also used for translation lookup in i18n.

**Factoid**: Python is a language similar to Java and C. It was built with a specific design philosophy (taken from "[PEP 20 – The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)":

- Beautiful is better than ugly
- Explicit is better than implicit
- Simple is better than complex
- Complex is better than complicated
- Readability counts

Because of these, though semi-colons are allowed as a statement delimiter, they are usually omitted in favor of using multiple lines for readability. Also, line indentation is very important!

Comment: Anytime! I'm not gonna add anymore snippets (couldn't resist the Length 9 one!), since you're doing a great job with it already. Good luck!

Comment: length 6: it would return `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` (the last 6 numbers in the list)

Comment: Length 16: `l` does not have to be a list, it can be any iterable object; tuples, lists and generators for example all work

Comment: @Sp3000: I've used it with [restricted-source] challenges.

Comment: No love for the good old [`import antigravity`](http://xkcd.com/353/)?

Comment: It's worth noting that several of these do not work in Python 3.x:
range(x) returns a generator object in Py3, 
backticks for `repr()` no longer work, 
octal literals are now prefaced `0o` instead of `0`.
It's probably worth putting these notes in the answer.

Comment: hmm, I don't think it's really **similar to Java and C.** I mean, if it's similar to them, then it's no less similar to C++, LISP, Perl, etc

Comment: @SargeBorsch Why? Just because it doesn't use curly braces? Program design ends up looking similar, assuming you use an object-oriented approach. It's probably closer to JavaScript than those two, though, now that I think about it.

Comment: @mbomb007 Python uses dynamic typing, and is much more high level. Yes, JavaScript would be a closer language, however it implements OO very differently

Comment: You can just use "#coding:rot13" to save 6 characters. The "-*-" is an Emacs-ism.

Comment: This is a showcase, not code-golf.

Answer (score 89):

## JavaScript

This goes newest to oldest. Link for myself: [[edit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/44706/edit)]
**Length 52 snippet:**

```js
console.log([...new Array(5000000)].map((a,b)=>b+1))
```

This logs an array of five million consecutive integers to the console.

**Length 51 snippet:**

```js
console.log(require('fs').readFileSync(__filename))
```

A Node.JS quine this time, though it would fail any "strict quine" requirements, due to reading its own source code.

**Length 50 snippet:**

```js
a=new XMLHttpRequest;a.open('GET','file');a.send()
```

Finally! An AJAX request (using [Vanilla.JS](http://vanilla-js.com/)). We initialize, open, and send the request, but I ran out of room to add handlers and actually *do* anything with the result.

**Length 49 snippet:**

```js
msg=new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello World!');
```

Prepare a vocal "Hello World!". It'll be a little more work to actually speak it. We can also adjust the volume, pitch, rate, and accent. See [Speech Synthesis API on HTML5Rocks](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/01/Web-apps-that-talk---Introduction-to-the-Speech-Synthesis-API). [Not yet supported by Firefox, certainly not IE](http://caniuse.com/speech-synthesis).

**Length 48 snippet:**

```js
function repeat(){setTimeout(repeat,48)}repeat()
```

Simulate `setInterval` by recursively `setTimeout`ing.

**Length 47 snippet:**

```js
module.exports=function MyModule(a) {this.a=a};
```

NodeJS again, but the principle is the same everywhere in JS. This is a very basic constructor function, which creates an object with one property (`a`). Setting `module.exports` exports the function for use by `require()`-ing it.

**Length 46 snippet:**

```js
canvas.getContext('2d').fillRect(46,46,46,46);
```

This requires a `<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>` element. It takes advantage of the fact that elements with IDs are populated as global variables, so the element is accessible as `canvas` from JS. Then we fill it with a 46x46 square at x=46, y=46.

**Length 45 snippet:**

```js
JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('jsn'))
```

Back to Node. Here, we parse a JSON file named `jsn` from the current directory.

**Length 44 snippet:**

```js
(a=document.createElement('a')).href="/url";
```

Building on #39. Now we create an element and assign an attribute. It still isn't in the DOM though.

**Length 43 snippet:**

```js
sq=[1,2,3,4,5].map(function(n){return n*n})
```

Creates an array of the first 5 squares, using `map()`.

**Length 42 snippet:**

```js
six="1+5",nine="8+1";eval(six+' * '+nine);
```

This works on the same principle as [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21887/32376), but JS lacks `#define` and so ends up uglier. It returns, of course, [the answer to life, the universe, and everything](https://www.google.com/?q=the+answer+to+life+the+universe+and+everything).

**Length 41 snippet:**

```js
c=function(){var i;return function(){}}()
```

The beginning of a closure. `c` is now a function (the internal one) with access to the internal variable `i`, but it doesn't do anything.

**Length 40 snippet:**

```js
$('p').click(function(){$(this).hide()})
```

[We are totally dropping those paragraphs and using jQuery.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/259693)

**Length 39 snippet:**

```js
script=document.createElement('script')
```

This is the beginning of adding a new external script. Create an empty `<script>` element, and keep a reference to it.

**Length 38 snippet:**

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('abc')
```

Find all the the `.abc` elements in the document. Of course, with jQuery, it's only `$('.abc')`...

**Length 37 snippet:**

```js
b=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a={3:7}))
```

Creates two identical, but decoupled objects, `a`, and `b`. If you would do

```js
a={a:1};
b=a;
b.a=3;
```

you'd end up with `a=={a:3}`, because `a` and `b` point to the same object. We use JSON to decouple them.

**Length 36 snippet:**

```js
(function f(){return "("+f+")()"})()
```

A [quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)). It prints its own source code.

**Length 35 snippet:**

```js
document.body.style.display="none";
```

See #32. This one just hides the document, without overwriting the contents.

**Length 34 snippet:**

```js
Object.prototype.toString.call(34)
```

Calling `Object.prototype.toString` is a good way to tell the type of an object. While `34..toString()` is `"34"`, the snippet is `[object Number]`.

**Length 33 snippet:** (credit for this one goes to [an anonymous user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/19862))

```js
+0%-0.&(v\u0061r=~void[{}<<!(0)])
```

Think this is not valid JavaScript? Better try it out... (use Chrome) ;)

**Length 32 snippet:**

```js
document.body.innerHTML="hacked"
```

Halp! Hazxxors!eleven!!11!

**Length 31 snippet:**

```js
a=[];for(i=0;i<31;i++)a.push(i)
```

No kidding, i have been waiting so long to be able to actually use a `for` loop! This one creates an array from 0-30.

**Length 30 snippet:**

```js
new Date().getDay()==1?"S":"E"
```

First time using the ternary operator. I couldn't fit more than this in 30 characters, so we only know if today is Sunday, or something Else. :P

**Length 29 snippet:**

```js
Object.keys(window).push('i')
```

`Object.keys(window)` will get an array of the global variables (properties of `window`). `.push()` will append an item to that array. Think this is the equivalent of `window.i=undefined`? Nope!

**Length 28 snippet:**

```js
setTimeout("a=confirm()",28)
```

Waiting 28 milliseconds isn't so useful, except for creating a new thread.

**Length 27 snippet:**

```js
document.querySelector('a')
```

It's a shame that DOM names are so long. I could only get a single link here.

**Length 26 snippet:**

```js
JSON.stringify({twenty:6})
```

See #16. *Now* we get actual JSON - a string.

**Length 25 snippet:**

```js
new Badge("Good Answer");
```

Assuming `Badge()` is a constructor function taking an argument... a [Good Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/good-answer?userid=32376) badge was just created!

**Length 24 snippet:**

```js
do {alert(24)} while(!1)
```

I actually don't use `do..while` very much at all, but some do. If this was an ordinary `while` loop, it wouldn't alert anything, because it's always false. `do..while` will always run at least once though, so we do get to see 24.

**Length 23 snippet:**

```js
window.parent==self.top
```

These all refer to the same object, generally known as `window`. If you call a function normally, there's also `this`. That's 5 ways of accessing the global object!

**Length 22 snippet:**

```js
for(i in self)alert(i)
```

Alert all the global variables. It happens to be that `self==window`. (See the next snippet.)

**Length 21 snippet:**

```js
"2"+1==21 && 2+1=="3"
```

Oh look, it's JS's casting rules again. This statement is true, btw.

**Length 20 snippet:**

```js
Math.random()<.5?0:1
```

Pick a random number from 0-1, and round using the ternary operator. Though it would be easier to use `Math.round`...

**Length 19 snippet:**

```js
[1,2,3].map(i=>i*i)
```

This one is new. Like, really new. It uses [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to compute the squares of 1, 2, and 3. Currently, it only seems to be supported by Firefox.

**Length 18 snippet:**

```js
location.href="/";
```

Like #15, but this time, it goes to the PPCG homepage, not SE.

**Length 17 snippet:**

```js
(function(){})()
```

It's the snippet from 14, but better! Now it's an IIFE.

**Length 16 snippet:**

```js
obj={not:'json'}
```

This explains one of my pet peeves. This is an *object*, *not JSON*! [JSON](http://www.json.org/) is a data-interchange format based on JavaScript objects, but taking a more strict format.

**Length 15 snippet:**

```js
open('//s.tk/')
```

Imagine that. Open up the SE homepage, using the http://s.tk/ redirect.

**Length 14 snippet:**

```js
function f(){}
```

W00t! Functions! Too bad there's no room to *do* anything.

**Length 13 snippet:**

```js
Math.random()
```

Generate a random number from 0 to 1. Want to define your own limits? Tough luck. (Not really, it's easy.)

**Length 12 snippet:**

```js
new Date<=12
```

This statement has never been true in JS. JS wasn't created until '95 (see factoid), long after 1/1/1970 00:00:00.012.

**Length 11 snippet:**

```js
Math.PI*121
```

The area of a circle with radius 11.

**Length 10 snippet:**

```js
if('j')9+1
```

In case you haven't noticed, i like doing something with the snippet number in the code. This one returns 10, and uses j, the tenth letter of the alphabet.

**Length 9 snippet:**

```js
[9].pop()
```

Make an array with one item. `pop` goes the <s>weasel</s> 9.

**Length 8 snippet:**

```js
document
```

The basis for all DOM work. But we can't do anything, because it's too long. :( Go jQuery!

**Length 7 snippet:**

```js
alert()
```

Oh boy! A function call! Finally getting to be able to do stuff!

**Length 6 snippet:**

```js
var x=6
```

Based on #3. Much better though, because now the global is *explicit*. :P

**Length 5 snippet:**

```js
[][5]
```

Even shorter than `void 0` to get `undefined`. BTW: `''.a` is even shorter; only 4 characters.

**Length 4 snippet:**

```js
+"4"
```

This will create the number `4` out of the string `"4"`. You can reuse these exact same 4 characters in a different order to do the opposite!

**Length 3 snippet:**

```js
x=3
```

Oh dang, we just made an implicit global variable...

**Length 2 snippet:**

```js
{}
```

What does this do? If you said creates an object literal, you're wrong. It's actually an empty block. Open up a console and try it! It returns `undefined`, not `{}`.

In 2018, `{}` in Chrome's console actually returns an empty object.

**Length 1 snippet:**

```js
1
```

That's it. Any number is a valid JS expression.

**Factoid:** JavaScript was originally called LiveScript. It was changed to JavaScript to capitalize on the popularity of Java, at the time (1995). Personally, they should have kept the old name; JavaScript has been a source of confusion since. Fact is, Java and JavaScript are about as similar as ["car" and "carpet"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/245068/3187556).

Comment: Snippet 33 doesn't work on Firefox. Is it really valid JS?

Comment: I find stringifying and reparsing an object to copy it so dirty. ECMAScript 6 introduces [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), so snippet 37 becomes `b  =  Object.assign({ }, a = {3 : 7})`.

Comment: @Oriol Yes, well, only Firefox supports it right now, so we have to stick to the dirty way for now. At least it's better than `eval(uneval(a))`, right? ;)

Comment: About #38, there's always `document.querySelectorAll("element#id.classname[attribute]:not(somethingwedontwant)")`. (Supports any valid CSS selector).

Comment: The #40 snippet itself isn't so interesting, but the comment is priceless.

Comment: "It takes advantage of the fact that elements with IDs are populated as global variables" - not in Firefox ;)

Comment: I think you missed `label:`, `NaN===NaN` and of course `Array(16).join('wat' -1) + " Batman!"`

Comment: This answer now has a score of 73, could you update it?

Comment: Snippet 33 doesn't work in chrome either D: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Keyword must not contain escaped characters`

Comment: The length 6 snippet appears to be 7 characters

Comment: You can, however, tell if the day is **S**unday, or **S**omething else in only 3 characters. :P

Answer (score 88):

## R

**Factoid:** The R programming language began as a GNU implementation of the S programming language. It is primarily used for statistics and related applications.

**Note:** Though not a requirement of the competition, every snippet here can be run on its own in R.

---

**Length 32:**

```r
`[.data.frame`(swiss,3,2,drop=F)
```

This looks a little mysterious... and indeed it should! There's a much better way to write this:

```r
swiss[3, 2, drop = FALSE]
```

That should look a bit more familiar. Here's what happens when we run either of these pieces of code:

```r
> `[.data.frame`(swiss,3,2,drop=F)
             Agriculture
Franches-Mnt        39.7
```

The `swiss` data frame ships with R like several others we've seen so far. It contains fertility and socioeconomic indicators for 47 French-speaking provinces of Switzerland from around the year 1888. The third row is for the province Franches-Mnt, and the second column is the percent of males involved in agriculture as a profession in each province. So in 1888, 39.7% of males in the Franches-Mnt province of Switzerland worked in agriculture.

When you extract rows or columns from a data frame using the simpler notation, R is actually using `[.data.frame` in the background. As we saw in snippet 24, pretty much anything can be defined as a function name so long as its surrounded in back ticks, so our snippet here is legit even though the function name technically contains unmatched brackets.

The `drop=` argument tells R whether you want it to drop the result into a lower dimension if possible. Indeed, if we say `drop=TRUE`, we get this:

```r
> `[.data.frame`(swiss,3,2,drop=T)
[1] 39.7
```

Where previously the result was a data frame, R now gives us a double.

---

**Length 31:**

```r
print(fortune("hadleywickham"))
```

The `fortune()` function is from the all-knowing `fortunes` package, which provides a variety of wise quotes from a variety of wise folks. This snippet will provide you with the following gem from Hadley Wickham (23) by printing to the console:

```r
That's a casual model, not a causal model - you can tell the difference by looking
for the word "excel".
    -- Hadley Wickham (commenting on an Excel chart showing student's SAT score
       increases with family income, without considering future covariates)
       http://twitter.com/#!/hadleywickham (February 2012)
```

---

**Length 30:**

```r
pie(rep(1,12),col=rainbow(12))
```

Who doesn't love a good pie chart? The `pie()` function will serve you up a freshly baked pie chart based on a vector of numbers. `rep()` creates a vector by repeating the first element *r* times where *r* is the second argument. The `col=` parameter tells `pie()` how to color the slices. The magical function `rainbow()` generates a vector of a specified length containing the hex codes for "equally spaced" colors of the rainbow.

What you have here is your basic "Amount of Each Color in This Chart" chart:

[image]

---

**Length 29:**

```r
summary(lm(mag~depth,quakes))
```

There are a few things going on here, so let's take them one step at a time.

`quakes` is a dataset that ships with R. It contains information about 1000 seismic events of magnitude greater than 4.0 on the Richter scale near Fiji since 1964. Two of the columns in the dataset are `mag`, which is the magnitude of the earthquake, and `depth`, which is the depth of the epicenter in kilometers.

The `lm()` function, as mentioned in snippet 28, fits linear models. It returns an `lm` object, or more precisely, an object of class `lm`. There are two ways to specify the predictor (or *independent* variable) and the response (or *dependent* variable), and I've chosen the formula method. This takes the form `response ~ predictor`. Multiple predictors are specified as `y ~ x1 + x2`. The objects in the formula are evaluated in the context provided in the next argument.

So what `lm(mag ~ depth, quakes)` is doing is fitting a linear model using ordinary least squares regression where magnitude is the response and depth is the predictor. It knows what `mag` and `depth` are because we told it that they come from `quakes`.

`summary()` is a generic function used primarily for summarizing the results of fitted models. It invokes a method particular to the class of its argument. Since we passed an `lm` object, it's actually invoking a function called `summary.lm()`.

Putting it all together, we get the summary of the linear model attempting to explain earthquake from earthquake depth. Specifically, this is what R spits out:

```r
> summary(lm(mag~depth,quakes))

Call:
lm(formula = mag ~ depth, data = quakes)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.72012 -0.29642 -0.03694  0.19818  1.70014 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  4.755e+00  2.179e-02 218.168  < 2e-16 ***
depth       -4.310e-04  5.756e-05  -7.488 1.54e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3921 on 998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.05319,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.05225 
F-statistic: 56.07 on 1 and 998 DF,  p-value: 1.535e-13
```

Notice how the first thing it tells you is the function call? That's because the `lm()` function uses `match.call()`, just like we did in snippet 28!

---

**Length 28:**

```r
f<-function(x,y)match.call()
```

R functions often like to keep track of what you tell them. Indeed, sometimes the command you've submitted is given back to you as an attribute of the returned object. (An example is `lm()`, which creates linear models.) Recalling the precise instructions is accomplished using `match.call()` within the function. This captures, or *matches*, the interpreted function call.

Here we've defined a function `f()` that takes two arguments and then tells you what it saw.

```r
> f(1,2)
f(x = 1, y = 2)
```

This is primarily useful when developing functions for general use (rather than just for you), like in package development. If you want to see an example of `match.call()` in the wild, look at the source code for `lm()` by submitting `stats:::lm`. One of the first things it does is capture the function call using `match.call()`.

---

**Length 27:**

```r
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

This may seem trivial, but it shows one of the reasons why R is so popular: It's very easily extensible through packages. And anyone can develop and freely share their packages!

`install.packages()` does precisely what its name suggests. It goes a-huntin' for packages using your default CRAN (Comprehensive R Archive Network) mirror then installs them on your system where R can find them. You can also have it install packages from local source code.

Remember snippet 23 where we used the `ggplot2` package? That package does not ship with R, but in just 27 characters you can make all of your `ggplot2` dreams come true by installing it.

---

**Length 26:**

```r
filled.contour(t(volcano))
```

The `volcano` dataset ships with R. It's a matrix containing topographic information on the Maungawhau (or Mt. Eden) volcano in Auckland, New Zealand. The rows of the matrix correspond to grid lines running east to west and the columns are grid lines running south to north.

For the sake of disorientation, let's swap the directions, so columns are now east-west and rows are south-north. We can do this using a matrix transpose, accomplished via `t()`. And why not make a contour map while we're at it? `filled.contour()` does just that.

[image]

---

**Length 25:**

```r
pmatch("s",c("n","size"))
```

The `pmatch()` function provides the magic behind all the partial matching we've seen so far. The first argument is a string which is compared against each element of the second argument, a vector. If there's a unique match, the index of the matching element is returned, otherwise you get `NA`.

The snippet here is a "real-world" example of the use of this function. Think back to snippet 13 where we used the `sample()` function. It accepts arguments `n`, `size`, `replace`, and `prob`, but only requires the first two. In snippet 13 we used `s=` as shorthand for `size=`. What's actually going on in the background is something like this snippet, where what we've provided is compared against what's expected. Since "s" matches "size" uniquely, it's totally legit to use `s=` as shorthand.

---

**Length 24:**

```r
`(`=function(x)9;2*(3-1)
```

A perfect example of something you shouldn't do! Ever!

You can assign characters as functions so long as you surround them in back ticks when defining the function. Here we told R that `(` is a function that always returns 9 regardless of the input. Like in many other languages, `;` can be used for including two commands on one line. So what we've told R is to define the function `(`, then print `2*(3-1)`.

Now, just about any person would tell you that 2*(3-1) should be 4 because you do 3-1=2, then 2*2=4. But we've told R that anything inside parentheses is 9. So while 3-1=2, we now have (3-1)=9. Then we get 2*(3-1) = 2*9 = 18.

Since awful things like this are possible, every time you submit code that contains parentheses in an expression (i.e. not a function call), the R interpreter actually goes looking for any functions called `(` regardless of whether you've defined `(` as a function. In general, the more you write, the more work the R interpreter does.

---

**Length 23:**

```r
qplot(Na,y=RI,data=fgl)
```

Finally enough votes for a (very) simple `ggplot2` example. The `ggplot2` package is an R implementation of the Grammar of Graphics, created by the legendary R deity [Hadley Wickham](http://had.co.nz). In general the syntax is very different from the base R graphics and takes some getting used to. However, `qplot()` is a simpler interface to some of the core features of the package and has syntax akin to `plot()` in base R. But unlike many of the examples I've shown you, `qplot()` does not support partial matching of function parameter names.

The `fgl` dataset comes from the `MASS` package. It contains measurements of properties of forensic glass fragments. Here we're using the variables `Na`, which is the percent sodium (Na) by weight, and `RI`, which is the refractive index of the glass.

[image]

---

**Length 22:**

```r
unique(presidential$n)
```

The `unique()` function returns a vector containing the unique values from its input vector in the order in which they appear in the input. The `presidential` dataset ships with the `ggplot2` package (27). (Thanks to Jemus42 for correcting that!) Its description:

> The names of each president, the start and end date of their term, and their party of 10 US presidents from Eisenhower to Bush W.

`presidential` is a data frame, and data frames contain columns just as lists contain items. Columns are referenced by name using `$`. This particular dataset has a column called `name`, containing the name of the president. But wait, we only specified `n`! Actually, this is yet *another* example of partial matching (13, 16), so `n` is totally legit.

Submitting this has an interesting result:

```r
[1] "Eisenhower"  "Kennedy"  "Johson"   "Nixon"  "Ford"  "Carter"
[7] "Reagan"      "Bush"     "Clinton"
```

Notice how Lyndon B. Johnson's name is spelled... Oops.

(Note: It has come to my attention, over a year after posting this, that the Johnson typo has been fixed. RIP humor.)

---

**Length 21:**

```r
integrate(dexp,0,Inf)
```

R has a built-in function for adaptive quadrature of functions of single variable over a finite or infinite interval. In R, infinity is specified as `Inf` for +infinity and `-Inf` for -infinity. The `dexp()` function is the probability distribution function for the exponential distribution. Since the support of the exponential distribution is [0, +infinity) and probability distributions integrate to 1, we would expect the result to be 1. Behold, an expected result!

```r
1 with absolute error < 5.7e-05
```

---

**Length 20:**

```r
deriv(~cos(x^3),"x")
```

R can do symbolic derivatives! This returns:

```r
expression({
    .expr1 <- x^3
    .value <- cos(.expr1)
    .grad <- array(0, c(length(.value), 1L), list(NULL, c("x")))
    .grad[, "x"] <- -(sin(.expr1) * (3 * x^2))
    attr(.value, "gradient") <- .grad
    .value
})
```

Looking through that you can see how it parses the function and uses the chain rule. Everything a function who took first year calculus should be able to do! The first argument to the `deriv()` function is an R expression (which is an actual R type) in terms of some variable, in this case `x`. The second argument is the name of the variable with respect to which the derivative is taken, here `"x"`.

Want to see something really neat? Assign the above to a variable, say `dx`. Define a variable `x` as a numeric vector. Then submit `eval(dx)`. R evaluates the derivative at `x`!

---

**Length 19:**

```r
c(matrix(1,3,3),"a")
```

In R, `c()`, short for "combine" or "concatenate," creates a vector from its arguments. The elements of vectors must be of the same type and all have length 1. But instead of getting mad at you about it, R will flatten an element with structure, in this case a matrix, and cast everything to the same type.

If the arguments to `c()` contain only a single type, no type casting occurs, e.g. if all arguments are logicals (`TRUE` and `FALSE`), the vector will be all logicals. If it contains logicals and numbers, it will be all numbers. If it contains character and anything, it will be all character. So our snippet gives us this:

```r
> c(matrix(1,3,3),"a")
[1] "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "a"
```

Note that the 3 by 3 matrix was flattened and the addition of "a" made everything into characters.

---

**Length 18:**

```r
(1-1/3-1/3-1/3)==0
```

A lesson in machine precision. This returns `FALSE`.

---

**Length 17:**

```r
example(readline)
```

The `example()` function will give you an example of how to use any built-in function. If you need to find out how to use `readline()`, R has a smug answer for you.

```r
> example(readline)

readln> fun <- function() {
readln+   ANSWER <- readline("Are you a satisfied R user? ")
readln+   ## a better version would check the answer less cursorily, and
readln+   ## perhaps re-prompt
readln+   if (substr(ANSWER, 1, 1) == "n")
readln+     cat("This is impossible.  YOU LIED!\n")
readln+   else
readln+     cat("I knew it.\n")
readln+ }

readln> if(interactive()) fun()
Are you a satisfied R user?
```

Way to be modest, R.

---

**Length 16:**

```r
acf(lh,t="part")
```

The `acf()` function returns the autocorrelation function for a time series. `lh` is a dataset that ships with R. Its description:

> A regular time series giving the luteinzing hormone in blood samples at 10 mins intervals from a human female, 48 samples.

In this example, partial matching is being used *twice*: once with the function parameter and once with the string value passed to the parameter. The full parameter name is `type` and the recognized values are `"correlation"`, `"covariance"`, and `"partial"`. Only enough of the string has to be provided to identify it uniquely, so we can use `"part"` for `"partial"`, which gives us the partial autocorrelation function (PACF).

[image]

---

**Length 15:**

```r
p3d(bunny,p=99)
```

Again we see the infamous bunny (11). The `onion` package gives us an even nicer way to view the most useful dataset ever, using the 3D plotting function `p3d()`. This calls the base graphics function `persp()` in the background, which takes a rotational argument `phi`. Using partial matching of parameter names (13), we can specify just `p=` in place of `phi=`.

[image]

---

**Length 14:**

```r
stats:::rgamma
```

R is open source but you don't have to be a wizard to view the source code; you can just type the package name and the function whose code you want to view separated by three colons (`:::`). This gives you the code that defines the `rgamma()` function, which generates random deviates from the gamma distribution. Submitting this gives:

```r
function (n, shape, rate = 1, scale = 1/rate)
{
    if (!missing(rate) && !missing(scale)) {
        if (abs(rate * scale - 1) < 1e-15)
            warning("specify 'rate' or 'scale' but not both")
        else stop("specify 'rate' or 'scale' but not both")
    }
    .External(C_rgamma, n, shape, scale)
}
<bytecode: 0x00000000098cd168>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Note that it uses a function `.External()`. This calls functions written in other languages, typically C and Fortran, the languages which comprise much of the foundation of R. Locating *that* source code does take a bit of wizardry. **Edit:** @Vlo pointed out that mere mortals can indeed view underlying C code invoked with `.Internal()` and `.Primitive()` using the `pryr` package. Thanks, @Vlo!

---

**Length 13:**

```r
sample(9,s=4)
```

This doesn't look like much, but it exemplifies a powerful concept in R: *partial matching of function parameters*. The named parameters in the `sample()` function are `size`, `replace`, and `prob`, but you only need to provide enough letters of the named parameter to identify it uniquely. Thus for `sample()`, you can use `s=` instead of `size=` since no other parameter names begin with the letter "s". The code here selects a random sample of size 4 from the integers 1 to 9.

---

**Length 12:**

```r
LETTERS[-pi]
```

There's a built-in vector called `LETTERS` which contains all uppercase English letters ordered alphabetically. Unlike many other languages, you can index a vector using a floating point number. Nothing too exciting happens; R just takes the integer portion. Using `-` preceding the index of a vector removes the element with that index from the vector. `pi` is a built-in constant containing--you guessed it--the irrational number π. So this removes element 3 from the vector and returns "A" through "Z" omitting "C".

---

**Length 11:**

```r
plot(bunny)
```

In the `onion` package, there's a dataset called `bunny`. Plotting it gives you what may be the most useful graphic of all time:

[image]

---

**Length 10:**

```r
????sample
```

Say you're REALLY confused about the `sample()` function and you desperately need help. Rather than the usual `?sample` to pull up the R manual page, you pound out four question marks. R hears your plight and attempts to help...

```r
Contacting Delphi...the oracle is unavailable.
We apologize for any inconvenience.
```

Alas.

---

**Length 9:**

```r
isTRUE(1)
```

At first this looks to defy the convention in the rest of the R base package to separate `is` and the following word in the function name with a `.`. However, that only applies to a logical test of whether the argument is of a certain type, as below (8). In this case, we're testing whether it is `TRUE`, which is not a type. This uses a strict definition of `TRUE`, i.e. 1 is not "true" in the usual sense. `isTRUE(1)` returns `FALSE`.

---

**Length 8:**

```r
is.na(8)
```

Unlike most other programming languages, `.` is a valid character in function and variable names. It does not denote any sort of method or heirarchy; it's just part of the name. The `is.na()` function checks whether its argument evaluates to `NA` (missing) and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

---

**Length 7:**

```r
stop(7)
```

This issues an error with the input as the error message. If called inside of a function, the function execution will stop. But calling it outside of a function won't stop the script. In this case, the output is `Error: 7`.

---

**Length 6:**

```r
x < -1
```

While this may seem trivial, it displays a major criticism of the assignment operator `<-`: namely, the meaning changes depending on the placement of spaces. As mentioned, `x <- 1` assigns 1 to `x`. Separating `<` and `-` with a single space as above changes it to a logical test of whether `x` is less than -1. For that reason, many prefer `=` for assignment.

---

**Length 5:**

```r
x<<-1
```

Similar to `<-` except `<<-` always assigns the variable to global scope regardless of the current scope.

---

**Length 4:**

```r
x<-1
```

R uses `<-` to assign variables in the current scope. This snippet assigns the value 1 to `x`.

---

**Length 3:**

```r
!0i
```

The `!` operator is R for "not," and `0i` is the complex number `0+0i`, AKA 0 in the complex plane. Submitting this statement returns `TRUE` since 0 is false.

---

**Length 2:**

```r
NA
```

This returns the special R value `NA`, which stands for "not available," denoting a missing value.

---

**Length 1:**

```r
T
```

This returns `TRUE`. In R, `T` and `F` are synonyms for the boolean values `TRUE` and `FALSE`, respectively.

Comment: Yay R `"!"(T)` !

Comment: @Vlo: `"!"(T)` evaluates to `FALSE`. However, the statement "Yay R" is never false. ;)

Comment: How do I upvote more for more entries???? "Locating that source code does take a bit of wizardry" is trivial for `.Internal` and `.Primitive` -> `pryr::show_c_source(.Primitive("sum"))`

Comment: @Vlo: I hadn't heard of the `pryr` package. Very cool! Thanks for pointing that out. I'm glad you like the entries so far, thanks for the support. :)

Comment: Hadley keeps on bringing us the goods. I also didn't know that you can subset with decimal values.

Comment: @Vlo: Hadley is the man!

Comment: Regarding 11: Doesn't work for me :/ http://dump.jemu.name/LWYXc.png

Comment: Regarding 14: Simply entering `rgamma` (no parentheses!) with `stats` loaded (default) works, too, no `:::` is needed – which I thought was only used to access non-exported functions anyway, or am I missing something? (I'm still fairly new to R)

Comment: @Jemus42 Ah, looks like you need to do `data(bunny)` first.

Comment: @Jemus42 I used `stats:::rgamma` specifically because it showcased the triple colon and didn't require an external package. (For a package that isn't loaded, you'd need `:::`.)

Comment: @AlexA. Thanks, works! Should have thought of that m) Also: Regarding 22: presidential is not in base, it's in ggplot2. But ggplot2 is practically base for the new kids :)

Comment: @Jemus42 Oh, good catch about `presidential`. I always have `ggplot2` loaded anyway. :D Looks like they fixed the Johnson typo since I made this post, which is good in a practical sense but sad in a comedic sense.

Comment: Why infamous? It looks so nice

Answer (score 77):

### [Brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck)

**Factoid:** Brainfuck (Also known as brainf*ck) was a experimental esoteric language for creating the smallest turing-complete language interpreter ever, created by Urban Müller, and is currently the most famous language of its kind. It has only eight commands, is easy to learn, but hard to use.

Brainf*ck has a tape base memory with 30000 cells and a a movable pointer, and can be visualized like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
    ^
```

With the `^` character representing the pointer, and the 0's representing the values for each cell.

Brainfuck has eight instructions:

```
Instruction  C Equivalent              Description
+            mem[ptr]++;               Add one to the value under the cell
-            mem[ptr]--;               Subtract one from the value under the cell
>            ptr++;                    Go on cell to the right
<            ptr--;                    Go on cell to the left
,            mem[ptr] = getchar();     Read a ASCII character from input and put the result in the value under the cell
.            putchar(mem[ptr]);        Write a ASCII character to the output using the value under the cell
[            while (mem[ptr]) {        Start a while loop: Continue to matching ']' when value under the cell is 0
]            }                         End a while loop: Go back to matching '[' when value under the cell is NOT 0
```

Brainfuck to C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char* mem = calloc(30000, sizeof(unsigned char));
    unsigned int ptr = 0;

    // Put your brainfuck code here, converted to the matching expressions under "C equivalent"

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Length 1 Snippet**

Read one character and put it in the current cell.

```
,
```

Memory (with input: `abc`)

```
0 0 97 0 0 0
    ^
```

**Length 2 Snippet**

Add one to the current cell, and shift the pointer to the right.

```
+>
```

Memory

```
0 0 1 0 0 0
      ^
```

**Length 3 Snippet**

Remove one from the current cell until it is zero; Set the current cell to zero

```
[-]
```

Possible memory:

Memory: (Before)

```
0 0 100 0 0 0
    ^
```

Memory: (After)

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
    ^
```

**Length 4 Snippet**

Comments:
In brainfuck, everything not a instruction is ignored.
For that reason the following program is a totally valid (but empty) brainfuck program:

```
Hey!
```

**Length 5 Snippet**

A simple cat program (Write input to output)

```
,[.,]
```

Thanks to tomsmede for his comment

**Length 6 Snippet**

Move the value of the current cell to the cell to the right (Assuming the cell to the right is 0, otherwise it would add the value of the current cell to the value of cell to the right):

```
[>+<-]
```

In general, people use this code for moving a variable though.

Memory: (Before)

```
10 0 100 0 0 0
     ^
```

Memory: (After)

```
10 0 0 100 0 0
     ^
```

**Length 25 Snippet**

Reverse a six character input and print it, followed by every ASCII character (N-1)..1 (where N is the value of the first input character).

```
,>,>,>,>,>,.<.<.<.<.<[.-]
```

**Length 53 Snippet**

```
main(){i=0;j=0;if(i>=0){if(j<=i)i+=1;i-=1;}return 0;}
```

This minified C program is also a Brainfuck program in disguise, and vice versa!  In fact, they (almost) do the same thing.  Here's the Brainfuck code without the "comments" (C code).

```
><+-
```

Let me explain the Brainfuck code (and C code).  As you can see, it uses two cells (`i` and `j`).  It increments the first cell (increment `i` by 1).  Then it decrements the same cell (decrement `i` by 1).

This is just a silly example of some source code being able to be compiled as two different languages and run (practically) the same.

Comment: `,[.,]` -- 5 characters, cat program

Comment: This may be the best "Brainfuck 101" I've ever seen.

Comment: length 6: that would put the sum in the right cell, and zero the left one. Not move, right?

Comment: Added a dummy variable to length 6 to better explain the concept. The program will in fact add cell #3 to cell #4 and make cell #3 0.

Comment: 58 votes -- could you update? :)

Comment: @Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ I will see what I can do when I get my hands on a computer!

Answer (score 66):

## C++

With its preprocessor, templates, lambdas, type traits and countless other complex features that no one can ever hope to understand in its entirety, C++ is rediscovered by each new generation of its standard. By exploiting its numerous ways to do things at compile time, one can write zero overhead abstractions like a library that allows physical units being attached to numeric datatypes in order to check their soundness at compile time (e.g. you can not assign the outcome of `kg`*`m` to `N`)

### Length 1

```
#
```

Usually introducing a preprocessor statement, `#` can stand on a line on its own. It essentially means nothing and seems to be so unknown that most syntax highlighters I see don't know it.

### Length 2

```
%:
```

Of course not everyone has a `#` key, so C++ is (well, it really inherited it from ancient C) generous to allow you to write it with this alternative token (aka *digraph*)

### Length 3

```
??=
```

This is a historical course on C++. These days not necessarily valid anymore, though implementations can support them, are trigraphs. This sequence is translated into `#` on those systems that support it, but to not interfere with raw string literals, it is not allowed within those. Implementations may chose to drop support alltogether.

### Length 4

```
auto
```

Is one of the newer (since C++11) inventions to make working with generic code easy. It is for deducing the type of an expression, and since C++14 it can even be used for deducing lambda parameters and the return type of functions.

### Length 5

```
 catch
```

Is a keyword that is also known from many other languages, present in C++, but the good idiomatic C++ programmer does almost never use it. With its constructors and destructors idiomatic C++ uses a principle widely called RAII (Resource Acquisition is Initialization) or how I like to sometimes call it more appropriately: SBRM (Scope Bound Resource Management). Due to classes like smart pointers, one can tie the lifetime of dynamically allocated resources (that is not only memory!) to other objects. When those go out of scope (e.g. by a thrown exception), these objects automatically clean up resources. This allows for exception safe and easy to use code that doesn't need to use `catch`.

### Length 6

> <strike>`[](){}`</strike>

```
[]{}()
```

As stefan mentioned in the comments, you can use `[]{}` as the shortest lambda object, thus this is the shortest form to *call* a lambda. The following text is for the old version:

is probably the shortest form of a lambda. Lambdas in C++ are objects (of implementation defined type) that are able to capture part of the scope they are created in (the [] syntax controls this), and are callable (the () syntax controls this). Their code (The {} part) has access to these variables as if they were within their scope. With their optional return type deduction and auto parameter deduction introduced in C++14, they are *the* tool to use for all the standard library algorithms that expect a callable (e.g. the third std::sort parameter).

### Length 7

```
virtual
```

Is the keyword to start using runtime polymorphism in C++, one of the basic blocks of object oriented programming. This follows the "don't pay for what you don't use" principle, wheras in other languages all functions are virtual by default. Being a multi paradigm language, it might be a surprise for people thinking "C++ is object oriented" to see programs or libraries that make almost no use of this keyword, e.g. because they follow the generic programming principle.

### Length 8

```
override
```

Working together with the virtual keyword, `override` is one of the later additions to C++ to make the compiler do more work for you. By using it, you express the intention of overriding a virtual function in the base class, and the compiler will error out if you did a mistake and that class doesn't have the specified function. In general it is considered good style if your code expresses the intention, rather than fiddle with bits.

### Length 9

```
constexpr
```

Being also a later addition to C++, `constexpr` allows the programmer to express for functions or variables, that they are known at compile time and should be computable at compile time. This allows these functions to be used in contexts that need compile time expressions (e.g. as template parameters or array sizes). Many standard library functions (if possible) are already constexpr so they can be used here.

### Length 10

```
for(i:c){}
```

Is a complete loop over a container, or container like construct that supports `std::begin` and `std::end` to get iterators (that includes C style arrays). It is basically equivalent to `for(auto __i = std::begin(c); __i != std::end(c); ++__i){ auto& i = *__i; }`. This allows for easy looping in generic code.

### Length 11

```
void f()&&;
```

Is a new way to declare member functions and the properties on the object they can be called on. In previous versions of C++ we only had the ability to chose `void f() const;` to tell the compiler to be able to call the function on const objects (thus without the const you can not call them on non-const objects). The same way we now have the `&&` syntax for r-value references being used to be able to call those functions on rvalues.

### Length 12

```
int main(){}
```

This is probably the shortest complete program that you can compile link and run. It will do nothing and return 0. This return is one of the many special cases you can encounter in C++. Normally returning nothing is undefined behaviour, but for the entry point function main, returning nothing means returning 0.

### Length 13

```
auto f()->int
```

is a rather new way to declare the return type of a function. Normally you would not do this if you already know the type, but there are plenty of situations in generic programming where the type depends on template parameters and the variables you use. Doing it this way allows for a somewhat easier access to these parameters as in `template<class T> auto f( const T& t ) -> decltype(t.foo())` instead of `template<class T> decltype(std::declval<T>().foo()) g( const T& t ) { return t.foo(); }`

Comment: I would suggest using `;` as an alternate 1-char snippet, because it's not a preprocessor macro and the fact that you can have a 1-character statement in C++ at all seems baffling.

Comment: `[](){}` isn't the shortest form of a lambda: As the list of parameters is empty, it may be omitted. Hence `[]{}` is the shortest lambda. Trivially, `[]{}()` is the shortest execution of a lambda ;-) http://ideone.com/k8fAvs

Comment: @stefan: indeed, I always forget it since it doesn't look function like then ;) I added it to the answer.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I absolutely hate it because indeed it doesn't look like a function.. ;-)

Answer (score 62):

## Regex

### Length 2 snippet

```
[]
```

**JavaScript**: An empty character class that doesn't match anything.

**PCRE**, **Java**, **Python `re`**, **Ruby** (tested on version 2.0): Syntax error.

### Length 1 snippet

```
.
```

`.`, called dot-all, is available in all flavors I had a chance to look at.

#### What does it match?

I̧n͟ g̨͜e҉̡͞n̵͢e͜͝r̷͝a͘l̢҉,̡͟ ̕̕`̴.̸́`̴̢̛ ̸̡̢m͞ąt̴̨c͞h̛e͢͡s̶͘ ͘a҉n̛͜͠ỳ̸ ͢c̵̡hár͘͝a̕͢ćt͘͠e͏̀͠r̷̀ ̴̕͢ex͝͞͞c҉ep̀t̛ ̕f̴҉o͟͜r̴͢ ͞n͏ę͟w̢̕͜ ͡l͝i̸̧n͢͡e̶.͟

**Java `Pattern`**: In default mode, dot-all matches any code point, except for these 5 code points `\r\n\u0085\u2028\u2029`. With `UNIX_LINES` mode on (but without `DOTALL`), dot-all matches any code point, except for `\n`. With `DOTALL` mode on, dot-all matches any code point. From Java 5, `Pattern` operates on code point, so astral characters are matched by dot-all.

**Python `re`** (tested on 2.7.8 and 3.2.5, may be different on 3.3+): In default mode, dot-all matches any UTF-16 code unit (0000 to FFFF inclusive), except for `\n`. `re.DOTALL` lifts the exception and makes `.` matches any UTF-16 code unit. In these versions, `re` operates on UTF-16 code units, so `.` only manages to match one code unit of characters in astral plane.

**.NET**: Same as Python. The dot-all mode in .NET is called `Singleline`.

**JavaScript (C++11 `<regex>`)**: In default mode, dot-all matches any UTF-16 code unit, except for these 4 code points `\n\r\u2028\u2029`. With `s` flag on, dot-all matches any UTF-16 code unit. JavaScript also operates on UTF-16 code units.

**PCRE**: Depending on build option, dot-all can exclude `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n`, or all 3 CR LF sequences, or any Unicode newline sequence in default mode. In default mode, the engine operates on code unit (can be 8, 16, or 32-bit code unit), so dot-all matches any code unit, except for the newline sequences. In UTF mode, the engine operates on code point, so dot-all matches any code point except for newline sequences. The dot-all mode is called `PCRE_DOTALL`.

**PHP** (tested on ideone): PCRE, compiled as UTF-8 library and `\n` is the only newline sequence by default. Dot-all mode is accessible via `s` flag.

**Postgres**: In default mode, dot-all matches any code point without exception.

**Ruby** (tested on version 2.0.0): In default mode, `.` matches any code point except for `\n`. Dot-all mode is accessible via `m` flag (!).

<sup>`s` flag is used to indicate Windows-31J encoding in Ruby.</sup>

---

### Factoid

Ŗ͞e̡͟҉ǵ͟͢e̴̢͘͡x̡́͞ ̛̀҉҉̢c҉̷̨a̸̛͞n҉̛͠ ̷̸̀p̴͠͡҉̵ą̧͜͢r̸̸̷̢͝s̢̀͡e̷̷̷͘͞ ̨̧̀H̨̧͜͜T̷͞M̷̛͜L͢.̴̡́ Repeat after me. R̶̶̢̧̰̞̲̻̮̳̦̥ͭͯ́̓̎͂̈ͯͤ̇͊͊͟ĕ̱̹̩̪͈͈͍̗͎̝͚̽̈́ͨ̐̽ͪͮ̍͂͐ͮͧ̔̏̓ͣ̀ĝ̵̢̢̖̤̜̭͔͊͒ͦ͛ͤ͗ͬͧͪ̾͘͟eͦ̄ͭ̑̾҉̨̨̝̬̹̘̭͔͟͢x̣̻͓̠͈͕̥̜͚̱̝̫͚̳̾̍ͦ̑̈́̋̌̉̎͊ͮ͗̄̆̒́̚̚ͅ ̸̦͈̥̬̺͇͂ͧͧ̃͐̎ͮ̌ͤ̈́̒̆ͣ̈́̏̔͊̐̀ç̨̬̪̳̦͎̖͕̦͔ͨ̃̿̓̈́ͅȁ̸̳̺̠̭ͮ̎̓̐͘̕͜͡ņ̨̫͔͍̬̤̘͎͚̣̟̦͍̜ͭͭ̈́ͦ̈́̽͗ͥ̑͝͡ ̸̛̖̝̻̻͎̍̄ͭ̓ͨ̋͋̈́͗̌̇ͤ͋ͬ͘pͪ̒̍ͫͤͭ͊ͮ̇̿̆̐̄̎͌̚͏̧͏͇̼͚̰͓̲͕̰̖̘̟̞̺̲ḁ̛͇̫̻̉̊ͣͭͤ̇ͨ́͘͠rͦ̂̈́̆͑͊ͣ̊ͮ̉̉͆ͧ̒͛̐̋̚͏̴̭̫̞̯̘̖͍̼̖̜̞̖̩͕̹̻̮̗͜͡͞ͅs̟͈̺͖̦̟̙̦͖̤ͬ̋͌̄͂ͩ̓̐̔̓͌̾̀̈͊̊ͤ̀̚eͫ̐͒̽ͯͫͨ͏̨̡̦̤̙͍̙̪̝̮̤͎̭̖̪̻͙͍͖͉̀́ ͉̭̫̰͔̝͓̼̮͚̻͎͎͉̐͗͗͊̇ͣ͒͗͑̆͐̎̐̀ͬ͛ͮ͝H̢̥͕̼͓̫͙̺̼̮ͣͦ̍ͨ͒̔̌T̪̲̦̻̦͖̞̤͒̑ͭ̐̑̃ͭͣ͐̎̒̉͊̀͜͜M̞̪͇͕̩͉͗ͧ̌ͯ͋͂̉̍ͭ̓̇̐̌͜͠Ĺ̷̨̳̘̯͚͓͛͌ͭ̉̍.ͯ͆̊̌ͯ̇̓̏͐ͪ̋̈́͑̕҉̷̠̰̼̤̲̀́

Comment: I feel bad for anyone who doesn't get the factoid's reference.

Comment: For length 2 in JavaScript, you might want to mention explicitly that it actually *fails* to match anything, as opposed to matching an empty string.

Comment: @MartinBüttner: Will change the wording on the next revision.

Comment: @robobenklein I know a secret medicine for your pain: Just enlighten us!

Comment: @flawr For those that don't know the famous question: the first answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags is what you're looking for.

Comment: You can read the Zalgo'ed text, but don't take them too seriously in both directions. It is plain wrong to follow the way of Zalgo blindly, but the Zalgo text is not wrong all the time.

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳, aren't you going to use all those votes to show us how to parse HTML?

Comment: @mbomb007: The number of votes is no where near enough. And I'm not an expert on Perl, which is the only language that is capable of doing so. However, you can take a look at this [HTML parser (?) written in Perl regex by tchrist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491) on StackOverflow.

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳, I was making a joke. :D

Comment: If I make an HTML parser with regex, what will you give me?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Feel free to do so. I'll give you some Internet cookie.

Comment: Meh, not enough reward. I get cookies on every website I go!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: tchrist has demonstrated that it is possible, so I don't know what I should reward you for.

Comment: He only demonstrated that it is possible, not that it is an actual usable tool. Like a state machine.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: If you think you are up to the task, then feel free to do so. When you are done, publish your work, blog about your experience and let people try out your tool. I'm not sure why you are asking me for reward. My stance is that there is time and place for everything, and I choose the tool which best fit the task. I'm not denying the possibility in anyway, if that's what you are getting from my post.

Comment: Probably I'm getting the wrong impression. Sorry about it. But it definetively can be done. You just need some clever trick.

Comment: You have 55 updoots now, will you add new snippets?

Comment: Can regexes parse zalgos?

Answer (score 59):

### J

PS: Snippets now linked to [tryJ.tk](http://tryj.tk) letting you play around with them running in JavaScript in your browser, without installing J.

PPS: I swapped order; this makes more sense for people joining in, and for future reference.

PPS: I think, due to time constraints, I will add one snippet a day

#### factoid:

[J](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/FrontPage) is a descendant of APL (see [here](http://keiapl.org/rhui/remember.htm#sec1) for the family history) minus the funny character set.

#### [Length 1 snippet](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=_)

```
_
```

J uses `_` both as [infinity and as negative indicator](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d030.htm), when attached to number literals (opposed to the verb `-`).

#### [Length 2 snippet](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=a.)

```
a.
```

`a.` is called [Alphabet](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Vocabulary/adot), containing all 1 byte characters. As such J does not contain functions like `atoi`, since they are simple look-ups in the alphabet: `a. i. 'z' =122`

#### [Length 3 snippet](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=i.9)

```
i.9
```

[`i.`](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/didot.htm) is for Integers, when used *monadically* (ie. only one argument, the right one, usually called y). When used *dyadically* it serves as *index of*, as in the example above.

#### [Length 4 snippet](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=!!6x)

```
!!6x
```

J supports [arbitrary precision integer and rational numbers](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dcons.htm). This calculates the factorial of the factorial of 6 (a 1747 digit number).

#### [Length 5 snippet](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=%5E.%5E%3A_%20%5D3)

```
^.^:_
```

A dense one... First, verbs (as J calls functions) are organized by theme. All ^ verbs are tied to exponentiation. `^` for [exponentiation](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d200.htm) (and `exp` when used monadically, `^.` for [logarithms](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d201.htm). `^:` is a special one, the [Power](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d202n.htm) conjunction (a higher order function), which applies a function a number of times. When right the argument is infinity (`_`) it executes its left argument (in the example `^.`) on its own output till it converges. In effect, `^.^:_`  is a verb solving `x = ln(x)` when applied to any argument but 1, yielding `0.318132j1.33724`.

#### [Length 6 snippet](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=%5E0j1p1)

```
^0j1p1
```

or equivalently

```
^o.0j1
```

[Euler's Identity](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Euler%27s%20Identity) in J. As cited above, `^` is `exp()`. Apart from arbitrary precision integers and rationals, it also supports powers of pi and complex numbers, and combinations hereof as literals. `0j1p1` means `(0 + j) * pi ^ 1`.

#### [Length 7 snippet](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=%2B%2F%26.%3A*%3A%203%204%205%206)

```
+/&.:*:
```

A verb taking the 2-norm of any vector. This demonstrates 2 things:

- the [Insert](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d420.htm) adverb turns the Add verb `+` into Sum by inserting it between each element of its argument. Hence `(0+1+2+3) = +/ i.4` .
- The conjunction [Under](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d631.htm) when used as `v &.: u y` is equivalent to `vi u v y`, where `vi` is the [obverse](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dbdotu.htm) (generally the inverse).

Yes, J knows about functional inverses.
Combining these makes the verb in the snippet equivalent to `%: @: (+/) @: *:`, or `sqrt(sum(y.^2))` in Matlab for instance.

#### [Length 8 snippet](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=(%24%23%3AI.%40%3A%2C)%205%20%3D%20i.%205%205)

```
$#:I.@:,
```

A [fork](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dictf.htm) is composed of 3 verbs without any reference to arguments. This allows what in J is called *tacit* (point-free) programming. A fork `f g h`, in the monadic case (as in this example) is equivalent to `(f y) g (h y)`.
As forks, multidimensional arrays are an intrinsic part of J. ["Indices"](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dicapdot.htm) returns the indices of ones in a vector, but does not extend to higher dimensions as such.
This example uses [Shape](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d210.htm), [Antibase](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d402.htm) and `I.@:,` as the 3 tines of the fork implementing I. for higher dimensional arrays, for instance:

```
 ($#:I.@:,) 5 = i. 5 5 NB. indices of 5 in i. 5 5
```

#### [Length 9 snippet](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=%3C%221%20i.4%206)

```
<"1 i.4 6
```

Boxed arrays are a data type in J, allowing to combine heterogeneous content (both type and size) into one value. Monadic `<` [boxes](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d010.htm) it's argument.
Rank is a central concept in J, and allows to automatically extend verbs towards arrays of higher dimensions. Both nouns and verbs have a rank.

*Noun rank* is the number of dimensions of any noun, which the verb `$@$` can tell you. For example `i. 2 3 4` is an array of rank 3.

*Verb rank* is the rank onto which a verb will apply itself. Every verb has an intrinsic rank which can be queried with the [Basic](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dbdotu.htm) conjunction. `v b. 0` returns 3 numbers for the monadic, dyadic left and dyadic right rank of the verb v.

A verb works on noun cells of rank equal to the verb rank, and replaces results in a noun `rank-verb rank` frame.
A verb's rank can be limited using the [Rank conjunction](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d600n.htm), as is done here, boxing rank 1 cells (rows) instead of working on rank _, ie. boxing the entire array. More info on rank can be found [here](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Rank).

#### [Length 10 snippet](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=(%5D%3B%20%3C.%2F%20.%2B%7E%5E%3A_%20)%20wtm%3D%3A%20_6%5D%5C0%202%205%20_%20_%20_%20_%200%204%201%203%20_%20_%20_%200%20_%20_2%20_%20_%20_%204%200%20_%205%20_%20_%20_%20_1%200%206%20_%20_%20_%20_%20_%200)

```
<./ .+~^:_
```

This snippet is a verb calculating the [shortest path](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Floyd) over weighted digraph.
It introduces minimum (`<./`) and the [Dot conjunction](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d300.htm).
The dot conjunction is a generalization of the matrix product,
which can be written as `+/ . *` . Generally, `u . v` is equivalent to `u@(v"(1+lv,_))` where lv is the left rank of the verb v. Or in words "u is applied to the result of v on lists of “left argument cells” and the right argument in toto". (See above for ranks)

As such the inner verb `<./ .+~` replaces item  `y(i,j)` with the minimum of `y(i,k)+y(k,j)` for all k.

`^:_` iterates this step till convergence.

Example, displaying original and shortest path distances:

```
(]; <./ .+~^:_ ) wtm=: _6]\0 2 5 _ _ _ _ 0 4 1 3 _ _ _ 0 _ _2 _ _ _ 4 0 _ 5 _ _ _ _1 0 6 _ _ _ _ _ 0
```

#### [Length 11 snippet](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=%3C.%40o.10x%5E99)

```
<.@o.10x^99
```

This snippet introduces *special code*: Some J code is supported by code specifically written for a certain use case, recognized at parse time, and optimized;
either for higher accuracy (as is the case here) or higher performance (see [Special combinations](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Vocabulary/SpecialCombinations))

This phrase gives 99 digits of pi (though shifted 99 decimal places). Special code depends on exact phrasing, what would normally be equivalent is not as precise as the snippet code: `<.o.10x^99` *looses* the extended precision.

#### [Length 12 snippet](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=%24%20%28%28%24-.1%3A%29%28%24%2C%29%5D%29%20i.%202%201%203%201%201%205)

```
($-.1:)($,)]
```

From time to time, you end up in situations where due to selections made in data,
there are singleton dimensions running in the way.
This handy utility, called squeeze in Matlab, squeezes out all singleton dimensions.
The left tine of the fork `($-.1:)` yields all dimensions without the ones, while the middle one ($,)
reshapes the raveled array to the dimensions retained. The right tine `]` serves just to make this a fork, and references the right argument.

#### [Length 13 snippet](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=(_2%20%2B%20*%3A)%20(1%20%3A%27-u%25u%20d.%201%27)%5E%3A_%20%5D%201)

```
1 :'-u%u d.1'
```

[Newton's Method](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Newton%27s%20Method) finds an approximation of a root of a differentiable function.
This [explicit adverb](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Vocabulary/Modifiers) is to be applied to the function of which the root is sought, and represents one step of the iterative procedure.
`u` is the argument referencing the function, being replaced the moment the adverb is applied. `d.`  is a conjunction deriving functions symbolically, and might here be replaced by `D.` which does the same numerically (but differs when applied to higher rank functions). The result is a [hook](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Vocabulary/hook) subtracting the [fork](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Vocabulary/fork) ( `u` divided by its derivative) from the argument.

For example:

```
(_2 + *:) (1 :'-u%u d. 1')^:_ ] 1 NB. root of x^2-1; ] is there to avoid combining _ and 1 into an array.
```

#### [Length 14 snippet](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=(%25-.-*%3A)t.i.10)

```
(%-.-*:)t.i.10
```

First 10 numbers of the [Fibonacci series](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Fibonacci%20Sequence) by Taylor expansion of
`x / (1 - x - x^2)`. Analyzing the hook `%-.-*:` gives  `(y % (-.-*:) y) =  (y % ( (1 - y) - *: y)`.

#### [Length 15 snippet](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=(%23%7B.%2B%2F%2F.)!%2F%7Ei.9)

```
(#{.+//.)!/~i.9
```

Another take on Fibonacci series. This time from another angle; starting from Pascale's triangle '!/~i.9' .

`/` when used dyadically means [Table](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d420.htm), applying the verb it's bound to between each cell of it's arguments, yielding a table of the operation between arguments x and y.
In this case `!` used dyadically, as [Combination (or Out of)](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d410.htm). `~` makes the verb [Reflexive](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d220v.htm), ie. use it's right argument as the left one too.

The adverb `/.` is an odd one, it applies it's verb along the anti-diagonals of an array (ie. [try `</.!/~i.5` here](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=%3C%2F.%20!%2F%7E%20i.5) )

So this snippet takes the sums on the 9 first anti-diagonals on the Pascal's triangle, which happens to be another occurrence Fibonacci series.

#### [Length 16 snippet](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=(%3B%2F%40%7E.%2C.%3C%220%40%23%2F.%7E)%201%202%203%202%203%202%203%202%203%201%203)

```
;/@~.,. <"0@#/.~:
```

Ok, I added a space just to get to 16 :). This snippet demonstrates a fork using [Key](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d421.htm):
listing all items in the argument and their frequencies.

`x u/. y` applies u to y in chunks where x is unique, or in J : `(=x) u@# y`, where `=` is [Self-Classify](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d000.htm),
which generates a boolean array containing 1's in positions where they appear in the `nub` [~.](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d221.htm)
Here it's applied reflexively, hence executing [Tally](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d400.htm)
on each unique item in y, counting the number of appearances.

As most verbs in J keep the nub order (order of appearance of new unique items, opposed to for instance `unique` in Matlab, which sorts its argument) this can be used for [Stiching](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d321.htm) the items
to their frequencies as is done here. `;/@~.` is used to make a boxed list of all items.

Note that because the prevasive concept of [Rank](http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/rank.htm), this code works [for any dimensionality](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=(%3B%2F%40%7E.%2C.%3C%220%40%23%2F.%7E)%20%3F%20100%202%202%242).

#### [Length 17 snippet](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=%5Dn%3D%3A%20(p%3D%3A%3F!9)%20*.%2F%20%40%3A(%23%26%3E)%40C.%40A.%20i.9)

```
*./ @:(#&>)@C.@A.
```

J supports a few primitives specifically about permutations:

- [Anagram A.](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dacapdot.htm) Monadically it finds the Anagram index, dyadically, it applies the permutation
  specified by the anagram index in the left argument to the right argument.
- [Cycle - Permute C.](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dccapdot.htm)
  converts between direct and cycle representation of permutations.

This snippet is a verb that takes an anagram index to the left (between 0 and `!#y`) and right argument y an array to permute.
Afterwards, it computes the [LCM](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d111.htm) `*./` of the cycle lengths `#&>`, ie. the period after which you get the original array back:

```
]n=: (p=:?!9) *./ @:(#&>)@C.@A. i.9 NB. period of a random permutation
p&A.^:n i.9 NB. applies permutation n times.
```

#### [Length 21](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=%28bins%3D%3A%28%25%7E%3E%3A%40i.%2910%29%20%28%20%5B%20%28graph%3D%3A%28%2C%26%22%3A%220%201%20%27%23%27%23%220%201%7E%5D%29%29%20%28hist%3D%3A%3C%3A%40%28%23%2F.%7E%29%40%28i.%40%23%40%5B%20%2C%20I.%29%29%20%29%20%28%2B%2F%25%23%29%20%3F5%20200%20%24%200)

```
<:@(#/.~)@(i.@#@[,I.)
```

This little verb comes from the "stats/base" add-on, and is called [*histogram*](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Histogram).
It does exactly that, given a list of bin starts, sums all occurrences of data between in the interval `]bn-1,bn]` where bn is the start of bin number n.

It exploits [Interval Index `I.`](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dicapdot.htm) for finding the interval of:

> If y has the shape of an item of x , then x I. y is the least non-negative j such that j{x follows y in the ordering, or #x if y follows {:x in the ordering or if x has no items.

Making the totals of each interval is done using [key](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d421.htm) as highlighted in snippet 16.

The snippet linked to on tryj.tk demonstrates the central limit theorem using this histogram:

```
(bins=:(%~>:@i.)10) ( [ (graph=:(,&":"0 1 '#'#"0 1~])) (histogram=:<:@(#/.~)@(i.@#@[,I.)) ) (+/%#) ?5 200 $ 0
```

#### [Length 22](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=%28%27abcd%27%3B1%202%203%204%29%20%28%3D%2C%26%28%2B%2F%29%28%7E%3A%23%5B%29e.%26%7E.%7E%3A%23%5D%29each%20%28%27bacd%27%3B4%201%202%203%29)

```
=,&(+/)(~:#[)e.&~.~:#]
```

Fun in J. This implements a mastermind engine, taking a secret array as left argument, and a guess as the right. The values returned are the number of white and black pegs. Taken apart:

```
NB.   ExactMatch: checks where digits correspond:
ExactMatch =: =

NB.   GoodDigitWrongPlace: Copies non-matched numbers from both arguments (left and right
NB.   pairs of parentheses, and checks them for same elements(e.), after eliminating
NB.   doubles in both (&~.)
GoodDigitWrongPlace =: (~: # [) (e.&~.) (~: # ])

NB.   Piecing the conditions together, after summing the booleans:
mm =: ExactMatch ,&(+/) GoodDigitWrongPlace
```

To be used like

```
secret (=,&(+/)(~:#[)e.&~.~:#]) guess
```

Where `secret` and `guess` are any array. It works with any data type actually.

Comment: Well, either you get an unreadable heap of weird symbols, or you get an unreadable heap of ASCII symbols. Pick your poison.

Comment: @JanDvorak All languages are unreadable until you learn them. ;-)

Comment: I used to think long, descriptive names aid code comprehension. Then I [was](https://github.com/Herzult/SimplePHPEasyPlus) [enlightened](https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition).

Comment: @Gareth But not all are unreadable even *after* you learned them. Not gonna name any names.

Answer (score 50):

### [RPL (Redstone Programming Language)](http://tossha.com/rpl/) [and Minecraft]

This is a big stretch on whether or not we can consider this a real programming language or not, but we will try anyway. And, as these two "languages" are practically the same, I will combine them, sometimes post snippets in "Minecraft" language (redstone, etc) and sometimes in RPL. Also, since many snippets will be in Minecraft, I will post links to the pictures rather than the pictures themselves to save space. Additionally, all snippets will be of programming concepts in Minecraft, not general redstone (i.e. no redstone doors will appear). Characters will be counted in bytes (in RPL) or as according to [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7397/36670) (in Minecraft).

#### Factoid:

RPL is a programming language by [Tossha the Inventor](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvH7xdcFYPpCYXHBX2TzUmA) that converts code into Minecraft redstone and command blocks. It can do input and output, loops, integer manipulation, trig functions, roots, and more.

#### Length 1:

A button (1 byte) is the simplest form of input in Minecraft. It also can start or stop a "program". Similarly, a lever (also 1 byte) is another form of input, and can also be used to both start and stop the program as it has an "on" and "off" state. Something to remember is that Minecraft is literally a 3D programming language, so where the button/lever is place in the program can make a huge difference.

#### Length 2:

A button attached to a redstone lamp is pretty much your *very basic* cat program. It takes the input (with a button or lever, either `0` or `1` (`off` or `on`)) and outputs it in the form as light from the lamp as either `0` or `1` (`off` or `on`).

[image]

### Length 3:

As seen below, this one of the shortest source-code modifying programs (as you can modify the source at runtime with Minecraft!). Now, this specific one really has no use, but the concept can be combined with others to create some awesome programs (as to come with more upvotes). When run, this program removes its source of input, and makes itself unable to be run again.
[image]

### Length 4

This "snippet" actually shows two concepts: delay, and the NOT gate. Delay is made using certain redstone elements that have a *redstone-tick* delay. A redstone-tick is equal to one-tenth of a second. Different redstone components have different delays: a torch has a 1rt delay (1 redstone-tick), a comparator has a 1rt delay, a repeater can have a 1, 2, 3, or 4rt delay, depending on how it is set up. In this example, the redstone repeater is set to a 4rt delay.

Next is the NOT gate. The NOT gate takes an input an inverts it. So in this set up, the output will be on if the input is off, and the output will be off if the input is on.

### Length 5

The OR gate is very easy to accomplish in Minecraft. Two inputs are connected to the same output. That is it. No funny trickery or anything, it's pretty simple.

[image]

### Length 6

Here is a tip for compacting your "code". If you know the signal strength of two inputs are small enough to not interfere with the corresponding outputs, you can wire the redstone right nect to each other. In the example below, there is a simple hopper timer, which transfers items back and forth in about 0.5s in each hopper, conncected to comparators that output a signal strength of 1. This means that the two ouputs will not interfere with each other. In the example, the lamps are there for demonstration purposes only and don't count towards the total block count.

[image]

Comment: I can haz more programs? ;)

Comment: @ETHproductions,, I am currently in the process of preparing for finals, so I do not have much time at the moment. However, I should have it updated by Friday.

Comment: That's OK. There's no rush.

Comment: You haz 13 upvotes, I can haz 10 moar programs?

Comment: None of your programs are actually written in RPL, so don't pass it off as such. This is purely Minecraft "code".

Comment: You have a deficit of 14 programs m8. I'd like to see what you have in mind ;)

Comment: You haz 21 upvotes, I can haz 15 moar programs?

Comment: You haz 29 upvotes, I can haz 23 moar programs?

Comment: You haz 36 upvotes, I can haz 20 moar programs?

Comment: You haz 37 upvotes, I can haz 31 moar programs?

Answer (score 48):

## GNU Sed

I am self-imposing a more restrictive requirement - all snippets will be complete `sed` programs.

#### Factoid

`sed` *is* a Turing-complete language. [Here is a proof.](http://web.archive.org/web/20150217125442/http://robertkotcher.com/sed.html)

#### Length 0 Snippet

I don't think a length 0 snippet is strictly required, but since it actually does something in sed, here it is:

Sed is the "Stream EDitor", i.e. it reads the stream (line-by-line) from STDIN, edits, then outputs to STDOUT. The zero-length sed program simply copies STDIN to STDOUT. Thus the `cat` utility may be emulated by sed. The following are equivalent:

```
cat a.txt b.txt > c.txt
```

and

```
sed '' a.txt b.txt > c.txt
```

#### Length 1 Snippet

```
=
```

This sed program prints the line number of each line to STDOUT. This is approximately equivalent to:

```
nl
```

or

```
cat -n
```

although the sed version puts the line number on its own line.

#### Length 2 Snippet

```
5q
```

Copies STDIN to STOUT and `q`uits after line 5. This is equivalent to:

```
head -n5
```

You might be starting to see a bit of a pattern here - `sed` can be used to emulate many of the standard coreutils tools.

#### Length 3 Snippet

```
iHi
```

`i`nserts "Hi\n" before every line. Meh.

#### Length 4 Snippet

```
/a/d
```

A lot of sed's power is in its regex capability. This program causes all lines matching the regex `a` to be `d`eleted from the stream. All other lines will still be output to STDOUT. This is equivalent to:

```
grep -v "a"
```

#### Length 5 Snippet

```
:l;bl
```

This is an infinite loop. We all love CPU-hogging infinite loops. Defines a label `l`, then `b`ranches (jumps) to it. Ad infinitum.

#### Length 6 Snippet

```
N;/a/d
```

The `N` command is very useful when you want information on lines `N`ext to what you're looking for; it appends an extra line to the pattern space. This will remove any pair of lines (starting from the first line) that match a regex `a`

#### Length 7 Snippet

```
s/a/A/g
```

By default, sed applies `s` commands such that it will match just the first occurrence on each line. If you need it to match (and substitute) every occurrence on a line, then the `g` flag at the end of the `s` command will do this.

#### Length 8 Snippet

```
y/01/10/
```

The little used `y` command is similar to the `tr` shell utility (though not quite as flexible). This program will switch all `0`s with `1`s and vice versa.

#### Length 9 Snippet

```
1!G;$p;h
```

This snippet is 8 bytes, but requires the -n parameter for sed to suppress default output. As per standard code-golf rules, I'm counting this as 9. This uses something called the 'hold space', which is essentailly a place to store something you want later. `1!` means 'on every line but the first', `G` appends the hold space to the pattern space, `$p` means `p`rint when on the last line, and `h` replaces the hold space with the current pattern space for us to `G`rab on the next cycle. So:

```
sed -n '1!G;$p;h'
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
tac
```

#### Length 10 Snippet

```
s/[ <TAB>]+$//
```

This is a revisit of the (old) length 6 snippet. This strips trailing whitespace (spaces and TABs) from lines.

#### Length 11 Snippet

```
sed -n '/a/{N;N;p}'
```

The `{` command does exactly what you think it does: it groups a bunch of commands together until there's a `}`. As with most commands, you can restrict it to a range or a regex; so this program will `p`rint lines containing regex `a` along with the two `N`ext lines following them.

#### Length 12 Snippet

```
'1,4d;9,/^$/d'
```

Speaking of restricting to ranges or regex, you can even do both at the same time. The first command `d`eletes lines 1-4 (counting the 1st line as line 1) and the second `d`eletes line 9, and then continues deleting until (and including) it hits an empty line.

#### Length 13 Snippet

```
'/i/,/a/s/a/A/'
```

(Read '/i/,/a/' as a range and then 's/a/A/' as the commnad) If you start a range with a regex, sed will start a new range each time you hit that regex. This capitilizes the first `a` after each line with an i. (it also capitalizes the first a on the same line as an `i`, if there is one; the second address is not checked until the range starts)

#### Length 14 Snippet

```
:l;N;$!bl;p;p;
```

The fisrt bit loads the entire input into the pattern space: define label `l`, add a line to pattern space, `b`ranch to `l` if we're not(`!`) the last line(`$`). In total, this program `p`rints the entire input three times: once for each `p`, and then again at the end with the default output.

#### Length 15 Snippet

```
'/a/,+9d;/i/,~5d'
```

GNU Sed adds some interesting ranging options in addition to the earlier ones. `,+#` will match `#` lines following the first address and `,~#` will continue to match until the line number is divisible by `#`.

#### Length 16 Snippet

```
'5,10w output.txt'
```

and

```
'r insertfile.txt'
```

Sed has a way to act directly on files with a command option (`-i` for edit-`i`n-place, with an optional backup file using `-i.bak` or whatever other suffix you want to add) but you can technically read and write to files inside your script. However, be careful when using them; `r`, for example, will output the entire file at the end of each cycle rather than appending it to the input as you may expect it to. To do this, just give each file name as another command line option like:

#### Length 17 Snippet

```
sed -s '1F' in.txt file.txt
```

The `-s` command lets you treat each added file as an entirely new group of lines, starting the line count over and reseting your ranges. This script, for example, will print the current `F`ilename whenever it hits the first line of a file, allowing you to see where one file ends and the next begins.

#### Length 18 Snippet

```
'N;N;P;D;P#comments'
```

Sed is pretty small in terms of built in commands, so we've almost covered everything. Several commands have a uppercase version which does things one line at a time for when you decide to load more lines into the pattern space with `N`: `P`rint up to first newline, `D`elete up to the first newline, etc. This is also a good a time as any to mention `#` makes the rest of the line into a comment, and will not be executed.

#### Length 18 Snippet

```
sed ':l;N;$!bl;e' srpt.sh
```

Coming full circle to rendering other commands in sed, this is roughly the same as `sh srpt.sh`. The first bit we talked about earlier, loading the full input into the pattern space; and the `e`xecute command runs the pattern space as a bash script and replaces the pattern space with the resulting output. In this example that means it just prints with the standard end-of-cycle output. You can disable `e`, as well as `r` and `w`, with the `--sandbox` command line option.

#### Length 19 Snippet

```
sed '/\\\//,//s///g' --debug
```

The `--debug` option is a great help whenever sed does something completely unexpected, as it shows each step sed takes in each cycle. It tells you, for each cycle: where the input is coming from, the new pattern space, the hold space if there is any, each command that is run with the results of that command, and the end of cycle output. It also renders your sed program in a more readable multiline form at the very start.

In this case, what happens is that an empty regex `//` is replaced with the most recently used regex when an empty regex wouldn't make sense. Since ranges are active whenever they are open, this is the same as just doing `'s/\\\///'`; ie it `s`waps each `\/` with an empty string.a

#### Length 20 Snippet

```
sed -nE 's/(a|b{2})/\u\1/gp'
```

The last thing I want to mention is the `-E` extended regex option, and a few fancy things on the `s`wap command. `-E` allows you to use characters for their regex meaning rather than their literal meaning. There are also many 'backslash escapes' you can incorperate into your replace string; used here are `\u` for 'next letter uppercase' and `\1` for 'first capture group'. Finally, many standalone commands have a 'flag version' that work at the end of a `s`wap statement, like the `p` which prints if there was a successful swap.

Comment: See also [USEFUL ONE-LINE SCRIPTS FOR SED](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt), which is basically how I learned `sed`

Comment: You have more votes. Can we have some more?

Comment: Your factoid 404'ed.

Comment: Nice, but please note many of these use GNU extensions and are not standard—specifically length 3 (standard would be `i\<newline>Hi<newline>`), length 5 (standard would be `sed -e :l -e bl` or `:l<newline>bl<newline`), and length 10 (which needs the `+` turned to a `*` to work at all).  Note that the length 9 snippet `-n '1!G;$p;h'` *is* standard, whereas `tac` is *not*.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard Yes - I've restricted this to GNU sed.

Comment: Your factoid contains code.

Answer (score 43):

## TI-BASIC

*[The language varies based on which calculator it is used on, but these will use the TI-84 unless otherwise noted.]*

#### Length 31 snippet

```
Menu("","1",A,"2",B
Lbl A
Lbl B
```

This demonstrates the use of menus. The one above is quite useless, as it does nothing, but they can be used to navigate the different part of a program. The first argument is the menu title, followed by pairs of options (the string displayed followed by a 1- or 2-letter label). Here is a more intuitive example:

```
Menu("CHOOSE VALUE","AREA",A,"CIRCUMFERENCE",C
Lbl A
Disp πR²
Stop
Lbl C
2πR
```

`Lbl` can also be used for branching with `Goto`. Menus have some limitations that make them annoying to use, however: There can only be seven menu items, and each title can be at most fourteen characters, so the whole thing fits on one screen.

#### Length 29 snippet

```
Real
√(-16
a+bi
Ans
re^θi
Ans
```

`Real` (on by default) places the calculator in real number mode, so calculations involving complex numbers throw a `NONREAL ANS` error. When put in `a+bi` mode, the calculator displays answers as complex numbers if applicable, so the second example returns `4i`. `re^θi` mode uses polar instead of rectangular coordinates, so it outputs `4e^(1.570796327i)`.

#### Length 23 snippet

```
If A≥9
Then
1→X
7→Y
End
```

This is just a simple conditional, although there can be an `Else` statement. `Then` and `End` are not required if it is just one statement.

#### Length 21 snippet

```
(-B+√(B²-4AC))/(2A)→X
```

Everyone's favorite, the quadratic formula. Stores the first solution to a quadratic equation as `X`, assuming a, b, and c are stored in their respective variables, as in *ax*<sup>2</sup> + *bx* + *c*.

#### Length 20 snippet

```
Shade(|X/2|-3,5-X²,0
```

This shades the intersection of the two functions, with several optional parameters: minimum and maximum values of x and direction of and distance between the shading lines.

#### Length 18 snippet

```
LinReg(ax+b) L1,L2
```

Here we calculate the linear regression equation, or the linear equation that best matches a group of points, with the x-values stored as a list in `L1` and the y-values in `L2`. There are many other regression options available, including quadratic, cubic, and exponential.

#### Length 17 snippet

```
dbd(1.2711,1.2115
```

This calculates the number of days between two dates, in this case January 27, 2011, the day this site started, and January 21, 2015, the day this was written. (That's 1455 days for the lazy.) The way to encode dates is a little strange: either DDMM.YY or MM.DDYY, leading zeroes optional.

#### Length 16 snippet

```
For(A,0,5
Disp A
```

This shows two parts of the programming side of the language. The first is your typical `for` loop, similar to `for(var A=0;a<5;a++)` in other languages. (You should also use the `End` command to break out of the loop.) The second is self-explanatory: it displays `A`, in this case 5 times because of the loop.

#### Length 15 snippet

```
Y1=|X³-4|
Y2=3X
```

Here are two examples of a well-known feature of *graphing* calculators: graphing equations. You can have 10 different equations graphed on the same plane, and there are many useful commands to find intersections, maxima, values of *x*, etc. Those equations look like this when graphed on a standard window:

[image: Graph]

#### Length 14 snippet

```
[[1,2][34,5]]T
```

The brackets are used to make matrices, and the `T` transposes the matrix:

```
[[1 34]
 [2 5]]
```

#### Length 13 snippet

```
dayOfWk(9,1,6
```

This finds the day of the week of January 6, 9 AD. The output is a number where 1 is Sunday, 2 is Monday, and so on. This particular date was a Tuesday, so the output is `3`.

#### Length 12 snippet

```
Circle(1,3,5
```

The first of the basic drawing tools, this draws a circle on the graph with a center at (1,3) and a radius of 5.

#### Length 11 snippet

```
randInt(0,8
```

This generates a (pseudo-)random integer between 0 and 8 inclusive. There is an optional third argument that tells how many integers to generate. There are several other random functions, including ones for normal and binomial distributions, one for a random matrix, and one for a randomly ordered list with no repetitions. `randInt` can be seeded by storing a number as `rand`: `2→rand`.

#### Length 10 snippet

```
4>5 or 2≠7
```

Here we have TI-BASIC's (in)equality and logic operators. The inequality statements evaluate first to `0 or 1`, and `or` returns true if either side is true, so this displays `1`.

#### Length 9 snippet

```
.656▶F◀▶D
```

This can convert from decimal to fraction and vice versa, which is very useful. There are also dedicated `▶Frac` and `▶Dec` functions that only go one way. Prints `82/125` in this case.

#### Length 8 snippet

```
lcm(14,6
```

This prints the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of 14 and 6, which is 42.

#### Length 7 snippet

```
getDate
```

Pretty self-explanatory, just prints the current system date as a list, in this case `{2015 1 19}`.

#### Length 6 snippet

```
√({4,9
```

Arrays (or lists) are surrounded by braces and separated by commas. This is similar to the `map` function of many languages, where it iterates through each element of the list and applies the operation outside the braces to it, in this case square root, so the result is `{2 3}`. Note that closing parentheses are optional, so they will be omitted from now on.

#### Length 5 snippet

```
4iii6
```

We've got a couple of cool things going on here. First, the real parts, 4 and 6 are multiplied, and then the imaginary parts are multiplied: `i^3`, or `-i`. These multiplied give `-24i`. This showcases funky-looking juxtaposition multiplication and TI-BASIC's handling of imaginary numbers.

#### Length 4 snippet

```
8°5′
```

This is 8 degrees, 5 arcminutes, which is converted to degrees as `8.0333`...

#### Length 3 snippet

```
8→T
```

This shows how numbers can be stored as variables, which is somewhat unusual because the number goes first, followed by the store arrow, then the variable name. As mentioned in the factoid, `θ` (theta) can also be used as a variable, and variables can only be one uppercase letter.

#### Length 2 snippet

```
4M
```

Similarly to Mathematica, you can multiply with juxtaposition, no `*` necessary. All variables are initialized to 0 by default, so this will output 0 unless you have stored something else to that variable (see snippet 3).

#### Length 1 snippet

```
e
```

This is the constant for [Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)), which displays as `2.718281828`.

#### Factoid

Variables can only store certain datatypes. For example, `A` – `Z` (and `θ`) store numerical values, `str0` – `str9` store strings, and `[A]` – `[J]` store matrices (2-dimensional arrays).

Comment: By the way, the lower case _`n`_ (not `n`) can also be used as a variable.

Comment: Interesting. I've never used that variable.

Comment: One can argue about `str0` being 1 character or being 4. All instructions in TI-BASIC are 1 character long.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I thought about that, but they are 1 or 2 *bytes*, and I decided to count characters normally.

Comment: I respect your decision. It helps a lot in this case. I really enjoyed programming on my oldie TI-83. (I've even designed a paint program in it!)

Comment: @Ypnypn Is there an Unicode codepoint for _`n`_ (not `n`)?

Comment: Two small things: First, I enjoy how you focus more on the math aspect of TI-BASIC than the code golf aspect; second, your length 16 snippet actually needs the End or the interpreter will not loop back.

Answer (score 41):

## Python

*([mbomb007](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44749/21487)'s post already has a plethora of Python snippets, but I thought I'd chip in with some quirkier facts)*

#### Factoid

Python is a dynamically typed language with an emphasis on readability.

#### Length 1 snippet

```py
1
```

In Python 3, the above is equivalent to `True` in the sense that `1 == True` (and also `0 == False`). Note that this doesn't necessary hold true in Python 2, where you can **redefine the value of `True`**.

#### Length 2 snippet

```py
<>
```

`<>` is an obsolete comparison operator equivalent to `!=`. It still works in Python 2 (although its use is discouraged), and was removed altogether from Python 3.

#### Length 3 snippet

```py
...
```

Python has a number of features which no builtin uses, but is there solely for the sake of third-party libraries. This `Ellipsis` object is one of them, and it is typically used for slicing. For example, if we have the following 3D [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) array:

```py
array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]])
```

then `a[..., 0]` (equivalent to `a[:,:,0]`) gives all the first elements:

```py
array([[1, 4], [7, 10]])
```

In Python 3 the `...` literal can be used outside of the slicing syntax, which amusingly allows you to use it as a "to-do" marker in place of `pass` or `NotImplemented`:

```py
def f(x):
    ... # TODO
```

#### Length 4 snippet

```py
(1,)
```

A one-element tuple in Python.

Python has lists (e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4]`) which are mutable, and tuples (e.g. `(1, 2, 3, 4)`) which are *im*mutable. One common use for tuples is as dictionary keys, since lists aren't hashable.

A common beginner mistake is to leave out the comma above, i.e. `(1)`, which is just the number 1 surrounded by parentheses. The one-element tuple is the only time you need a comma before the closing parens — it raises a `SyntaxError` if you try to put one in the empty tuple `()`, and is optional for tuples of length at least 2.

#### Length 5 snippet

```py
0or x
```

There's a few things going on in this snippet, so let's take a look!

`or` is like `||` in many languages. In Python, `A or B` short-circuits, returning `A` (without evaluating `B`) if `A` is truthy, otherwise it returns `B`. For example, `1 or x` always returns `1`, as `1` is always truthy, and even works if `x` is not defined. On the other hand, `0 or x` either returns `x` if `x` is defined, or throws a `NameError` if it isn't.

When golfing, we can usually drop the whitespace between a number and an `or`, such as `1 or x` becoming `1or x`. This is possible because `1or` starts with a digit, making it an illegal Python identifier.

*However* there is one exception — `0or`, which mysteriously throws a `SyntaxError`. Why? Because octal literals in Python start with `0o` (e.g. `0o20 == 16`), and the parser chokes when it reaches the `r`!

<sup>Note: In Python 2, octal literals may also start with a leading zero, e.g. `020`.</sup>

#### Length 6 snippet

```py
*x,y=L
```

This snippet demonstrates a special type of assignment in Python, where `L` is a list, tuple or any other sort of iterable.

In Python, you can "unpack" tuples and lists like so:

```py
a,b = [1,2]
```

This assigns 1 to `a` and 2 to `b`. This syntax is also used for multiple assignment, such as

```py
a,b = b,a+b
```

which is useful when writing a program that computes the Fibonacci series.

If the lengths on both sides don't match, then a `ValueError` is thrown. However, Python 3 introduced a new syntax, [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) (or more colloquially, "starred assignment") which allows you to do things like this:

```py
*x,y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This assigns `y` to the last element, 5, and `x` to **the rest of the list**, i.e. `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. You can even do something like this:

```py
a,b,*c,d,e = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

which assigns 1 to `a`, 2 to `b`, `[3, 4, 5]` to `c`, 6 to `d` and 7 to `e`.

#### Length 7 snippet

```py
zip(*x)
```

`zip` is a function which takes a bunch of lists and, well, zips them up:

```py
>>> zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

<sup>Note: In Python 3 a `zip` object is returned instead, so if you want a list like above you'll need to wrap the call in `list()`</sup>

It's quite a convenient function if you have two or more related lists, and you want to link up their respective entries.

Now say you want to *unzip* the list — how would you do so? We can try to use `zip` again, but unfortunately this gives:

```py
>>> zip([(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)])
[((1, 4),), ((2, 5),), ((3, 6),)]
```

The problem is that everything is in the one list, but `zip` takes the individual lists as separate function arguments. To fix this we introduce the `*` splat operator, which takes a list/tuple/etc. and unpacks them as function arguments:

```py
f(*[1,2]) ==> f(1, 2)
```

And the result is:

```py
>>> zip(*[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)])
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```

#### Length 8 snippet

```py
x='a''b'
```

The first time I saw this, I was a little taken back — what does it mean to have two strings next to each other? The answer was simple:

```py
>>> x
'ab'
```

Python merely concatenates the two strings! This is extremely useful for readability, since it allows you to break up long strings like so (note the surrounding parentheses):

```py
x = ('This is a very long sentence, which would not look very nice '
     'if you tried to fit it all on a single line.')
```

#### Length 9 snippet

```py
0!=2 is 2
```

You may already know that Python allows chaining of comparison operators, so `5 < x <= 7` is only true if `5 < x` and `x <= 7`. If you didn't know that... then surprise!

Anyhow, lesser known is the fact that, since `is`/`is not`/`in`/`not in` are also comparison operators, they can be chained too. In other words, the above code is equivalent to `(0 != 2) and (2 is 2)`, which is `True`.

<sup>Note: There are a few subtleties with the `2 is 2` half though, since `is` checks whether two things are the same *object*, not whether two things are the same *value*. Python caches small integers so `1+1 is 2` is `True`, but `999+1 is 1000` is **`False`**!</sup>

#### Length 10 snippet

```py
x=[];x+=x,
```

What happens when you add a list to itself? If we try printing `x`, we get:

```py
[[...]]
```

Fortunately, Python's `print` is intelligent enough to not explode trying to print recursive lists. We can then do a bunch of fun things, like:

```py
>>> x[0][0][0][0][0]
[[...]]
>>> x[0] == x
True
```

This feature also works with dictionaries, and is one way of creating data structures with cycles, e.g. a graph.

#### Length 11 snippet

```py
help(slice)
```

The `help` function is very useful for debugging in Python. When called with no arguments in REPL, `help()` starts a help session, in which you can look up documentation for functions/data types/etc. When called with a specific argument, `help` will give information on the related item.

For example, `help(slice)` gives the following information (truncated since it's quite long):

```py
Help on class slice in module __builtin__:

class slice(object)
 |  slice(stop)
 |  slice(start, stop[, step])
 |  
 |  Create a slice object.  This is used for extended slicing (e.g. a[0:10:2]).
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __cmp__(...)
 |      x.__cmp__(y) <==> cmp(x,y)
 |  
 |  __getattribute__(...)
 |      x.__getattribute__('name') <==> x.name
 |
 | ...
```

As for `slice`, as we can see we can create `slice` objects for indexing. For example:

```py
>>> L = list(range(10))
>>> L[slice(2, 5)]         # L[2:5]
[2, 3, 4]
>>> L[slice(2, None)]      # L[2:]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Another useful function for debugging is `dir()`, which returns all names in the current scope when called without an argument, and returns all attributes of a given object when called with an argument.

#### Length 12 snippet

```py
round(5.0/2)
```

What does this evaluate to? The answer depends on your Python version!

In Python 2, division between two integers results in integer division (i.e. `5/2 == 2`) whereas in Python 3 we get float division (i.e. `5/2 == 2.5`). However, this is division between a float and an integer, which should always result in a float. Why would we get different results then?

If we take a look at the documentation for `round` for both Python versions, we'll find the answer:

- In [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round), `round` tiebreaks by rounding away from 0.
- In [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#round), `round` tiebreaks by rounding towards the **closest even integer**.

In other words, `5.0/2 = 2.5` rounds to `3` in Python 2, but rounds to `2` in Python 3. Rounding towards the closest even integer might sound weird, but it's actually called [banker's rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even), and tries to treat positive and negative values similarly to reduce bias.

#### Length 13 snippet

```py
class C:__x=1
```

Being object-oriented, Python has classes. The above is a class `C` which has a single attribute `__x` set to 1.

We can access class attributes using dot notation. For example, if we have the class

```py
class MyClass(): my_attr = 42
```

then printing `MyClass.my_attr` would result in 42, as expected.

However, if we do the same and try to access `C.__x` as defined above, we get:

```py
AttributeError: type object 'C' has no attribute '__x'
```

What's going on? `C` clearly has an `__x` attribute!

The reason is that attributes starting with `__` emulate "private" variables, something which [Python does not have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes). Python mangles the name of any attribute starting with `__`, appending the class name so that name reuse conflicts are avoided. In the above example, if we were really determined to access that `1`, we would instead have to do

```py
>>> C._C__x
1
```

#### Length 14 snippet

```py
NotImplemented
```

Not only does Python have classes, it also has operator overloading. For example, you can have a class

```py
class Tiny():
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return True
```

where `__lt__` is the less-than operator. Now if we make an instance of `Tiny`, we can do this

```py
>>> t = Tiny()
>>> t < 1
True
>>> t < "abc"
True
```

since we've defined `__lt__` to always return `True`. Note that we can also do

```py
>>> 42 > t
True
```

but the following breaks:

```py
>>> t > 42
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    t > 42
TypeError: unorderable types: Tiny() > int()
```

Wait, how does that work? We haven't specified a behaviour for greater-than with `Tiny`, so it's not surprising that the last case breaks. But then how does an `int` (42) know that it's greater than our `Tiny` object?

Python has a builtin constant `NotImplemented`, which can be returned by a comparison special method. Let's try it out:

```py
class Unknown():
    def __gt__(self, other):
        # __gt__ for greater-than
        print("Called me first!")
        return NotImplemented
```

Now if we make an instance of our new class:

```py
>>> u = Unknown()
```

We can do this:

```py
>>> t < u
True
>>> u > t
Called me first!
True
```

As we can see, what happened for `u > t` is that Python tried to call the greater-than method for `Unknown` first, found that it was not implemented, and tried the less-than method for the other class (`Tiny`) instead!

#### Length 15 snippet

```py
x=[],;x[0]+=[1]
```

This is a bit of a fun one. First we assign `x` to be `[],` which is an empty list inside a tuple, i.e. `([],)`. Then we do `x[0]+=[1]` which tries to extend the empty list inside by the second list `[1]`.

Now, remember that lists are mutable and tuples are *im*mutable – what happens when you try to change a mutable object inside an immutable object?

```py
>>> x=[],;x[0]+=[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    x=[],;x[0]+=[1]
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Oh so it gives an error, I guess that's to be expected. But what if we try to print `x`?

```py
>>> x
([1],)
```

Huh? The list changed!

If you're curious about what's happening here, be sure to check out [this blog post](http://emptysqua.re/blog/python-increment-is-weird-part-ii/).

#### Length 16 snippet

```py
@lru_cache(None)
```

Just add cache! This is a simple example of a [decorator](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/) available in Python 3.

Suppose we have the following naïve Fibonacci implementation:

```py
def f(n):
    if n < 2: return 1
    return f(n-1) + f(n-2)
```

As most introduction to programming courses may tell you, this is a *very bad* way of implementing Fibonacci, leading to exponential runtime since we're effectively just adding a lot of 1s at the base case. `f(10)`? Runs in a split second. `f(32)`? Take a while, but it gets there. `f(100)`? Nope.

But if we cache the results, things should get a lot faster. We could always use a dictionary for the cache, but let's try something else instead:

```py
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(None)
def f(n):
    if n < 2: return 1
    return f(n-1) + f(n-2)
```

As we can see, all I've done is import `lru_cache` from the `functools` module and added `@lru_cache(None)` before my function. `@` denotes a decorator which wraps around a function, in this case for memoisation. `lru_cache`'s first argument is `maxsize`, the maximum size of the cache – here we've set it to `None` to indicate no maximum size.

Now if we try to use it:

```py
>>> f(100)
573147844013817084101
```

And it didn't even take a second!

<sup>Note: `f(1000)` leads to a recursion depth error, but that's a story for another time</sup>

Comment: What range of small integers does Python "catch" for the `is` operator?

Comment: @mbomb007 From [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/306353/2771429), it appears to be -5 to 256. You can try `-5-1 is -6` and `255+2 is 257` to test.

Answer (score 40):

## APL

### Factoid

APL (**A** **P**rogramming **L**anguage) started out as an interpreter for a formula notation devised by [Ken Iverson](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_E._Iverson). When the language was designed, people used teletypwriters to communicate with computers. The character set of these was limited, but due to their construction, one could put multiple characters into the same position to compose complex characters. This feature is heavily used by APL, contributing to its infamous reputation as a read-only language.

You can try out most of the examples on http://www.tryapl.org.

### Length 1

```
⍝
```

The character `⍝`, called lampshade, both for its shape and for the enlightment you get from its presence, introduces a comment. Historically, it was created by overstriking a `∘` (jot) and a `∩` (up shoe).

### Length 2

```
⍳3
```

The monadic (one argument) function `⍳` (iota) generates a vector of the first few natural numbers. For instance, the aforementioned `⍳3` would yield `1 2 3`, the vector of the first three natural numbers. On some implementations of APL, it would yield `0 1 2` instead, this depends on the value of `⎕IO`, the **i**ota **o**rigin.

### Length 3

```
5\3
```

As opposed to the monadic `⍳`, the dyadic `\` (expand) function copies the argument on the right as often as the argument on the left; thus, `5\3` yields `3 3 3 3 3`. You might want to play around with vector arguments (like `1 2 3\4 5 6`) to see what it does then.

### Length 4

```
A←⍳3
```

This assigns to `A` the value of `⍳3`. `←` (left arrow) is the assignment operator. An assignment doesn't have to be the leftmost thing in a statement; assignments are parsed like function calls and yield the assigned value for further use.

### Length 5

```
∘.×⍨A
```

A three by three multiplication table, that is,

```
1 2 3
2 4 6
3 6 9
```

This is a little bit complicated, so let me explain. `⍺∘.f⍵` (read: alpha jot dot f omega) is the *outer product* of `⍺` and `⍵` over `f`. The outer product is a table of the result of applying `f` to each possible pair of elements from `⍺` and `⍵`. In this example, `f` is `×` (multiply), yielding a multiplication table. The operator `⍨` (tilde diæresis) *commutes*  its arguments, that is, `⍺f⍨⍵` is equal to `⍺f⍵` and `f⍨⍵` without a left operand is equal to `⍵f⍵`. Without the commute operator this snippet would be `A∘.×A`. The outer product operator is very versatile; check out what happens if you substitute `=` for `×`!

### Length 6

```
{×/⍳⍵}
```

A factorial function. A pair of curly braces encloses a *dfn* (dynamic function), that is, an anonymous function (cf. lambda expressions). The arguments to a dfn are bound to the variables `⍺` and `⍵` or just `⍵` if the dfn is called as a monadic (single argument, as opposed to dyadic, two argument) function. We apply `⍳` to the right argument, yielding integers from `1` to `⍵`. The `/` (slash) operator reduces, that is `f/⍵` inserts `f` between the items of `⍵`. For instance, `+/⍳5` is just `1+2+3+4+5`. In this case, we reduce with `×`, yielding the product of the items of `⍳⍵`, which is just the factorial of `⍵`.

### Length 7

```
2×3*4+5
```

Yields `39366`. `⍺*⍵` (alpha star omega) is `⍺` raised to the power of `⍵`. APL has a very simple precedence rule: Everything is evaluated from right to left, all functions are right-associative. Operators bind stronger than functions and are evaluates from left to right. Thus, the expression above with explicit parentheses would be written as `2×(3*(4+5))` as opposed to the usual `(2×(3*4))+5`.

### Length 8

```
¯1+3 3⍴A
```

This snippet yields

```
0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
```

and demonstrates two important concepts: The first concept is the `⍴` (rho) function, which *reshapes* its right argument to the shape specified in its left argument. The shape of an array is a vector of the lengths of each axis in the array. The shape of a scalar is the empty vector. Thus, `3 3⍴A` reshapes `A` into a three by three matrix. The second concept is how addition is used here: We add `¯1` (overbar one), meaning negative one (`¯` is a prefix to specify negative numbers, while `-` is an operator) to an array. The two operands have different shapes, so the operand with the lesser shape is distributed onto the other operand, subtracting one from every item in the generated matrix.

### Length 9

```
+.×⍨3 3⍴A
```

`A`, reshaped to a 3 by 3 matrix, multiplied with itself. The `.` (dot) operator takes two functions and constructs an *inner product*, where the first function represents *addition* and the second function *multiplication.* A plain, old, matrix multiplication is `+.×`, a common variant is `≠.∧` (where `≠` is not equal and `∧` (up caret) is logical and) for boolean matrices; many interesting things can be modelled as an inner product with certain operators in place of `+` and `×`.

### Length 10

```
(.5×⊢+÷)⍣≡
```

(read: left parenthesis dot five multiply right-tack plus divide right parenthesis star-diæresis same) Compute the square root of a real using the [Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method). The left argument is the number you want to compute the square root of, the right argument is the initial guess for the square root. I originally wanted to provide a meaningful initial guess, but I ran out of characters (append `⍨` to use the number itself as the initial guess).

So how does this work? Let's start with the left part, `(.5×⊢+÷)`, first. This expression uses tacit notation originating in [J](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44684/26997) which was later ported back to Dyalog APL. Tacit notation is a bit hard for beginners, so please read this section carefully. An isolated sequence, such as `+/÷≢`, which the “normal” parsing rules do not resolve to a single part of speech is called a train. A train of two or three functions produces a function and (by repeated resolution), a function train of any length also produces a function. A train of three functions `fgh` behaves like `{(⍺f⍵)g⍺h⍵}`, that is, `f` and `h` are applied to the arguments of the resulting function and the result of these are applied to `g`. A train of an array and two functions like `Afg` behaves like `{Af⍺g⍵}`, this is, `g` is applied to the arguments of the resulting function and `A` and that result are applied to `f`. A train of two functions has a semantic, too, which is explained in the documentation but not used in this example.

In this particular train, one new function, `⊢` (right tack) is used. It behaves like `{⍵}`, yielding its right argument. Thus, the entire expression is equal to `{.5×⍵+⍺÷⍵}`, which is just the iteration step of the Babylonian formula. It is easy to see how tacit notation benefits the golfer; it allows you to shave of quite a few precious characters where applicable.

The last piece of the puzzle is the `⍣` (star diæresis), *power* operator. If the right argument is an array, `f⍣A⍵` applies `f` to `⍵` a total of `A` times. For instance, `f⍣3⍵` is equal to `fff⍵`. The count can be negative, in which case APL tries to infer an inverse function of `f` and applies that. If the right argument to `⍣` is a function, too, `f⍣g⍵` applies `f` to `⍵` until `(fY)gY` where `Y` is the result of the repeated application of `f` to `⍵`. Notably, if `g` is `=` (equal) or `≡` (same), `f⍣≡` computes a *fix point* of `f`. This is exactly what we need for the Babylonian method! We want to iterate until the result converges. Lastly, if `⍣` applied to a pair of things is invoked as a dyadic function, the left argument is bound to `f` on the left, i.e. `⍺f⍣g⍵` is equal to `(⍺∘f)⍣g⍵` where `A∘f` behaves like `{Af⍵}`.

Comment: You've got more votes! Can we have some more?

Comment: @luserdroog Sure, let me think of some more.

Comment: May I edit and extend this?

Comment: @Adám Yes, please.

Comment: `∘.×⍨a` [gives me a value error](http://tryapl.com/?a=%u2218.%D7%u2368a&run). Am I using it correctly?

Comment: @Cyoce Have you set `a` to something before doing that?

Comment: @FUZxxl I see you edited the `a` to be uppercase. That appears to have been the issue

Comment: @Cyoce Yeah, I don't know what I did there.

Comment: Shouldn't the result of the length 8 snippet be `3 3⍴0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2`? `A` was defined to be `⍳3`, not `⍳9`.

Comment: I've edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 39):

## [Jot](https://web.archive.org/web/20131101213211/http://semarch.linguistics.fas.nyu.edu/barker/Iota/)

Factoid: I can define Jot with 2 upvotes, and prove that it's Turing complete with 8 (not using lengths 4, 6, or 7).

### Length 1

```
1
```

This is an example of two functions in Jot. The first is the empty string, which evaluates to the identity function. The second is `1`, which is Jot's grouping operator. `1` evaluates to `λxy.[F](xy)` ([lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) notation), where `[F]` is the program before the `1` (here, the empty string). So, this program is the function `λxy.(λz.z)(xy)` which simplifies to `λxy.xy`.

### Length 2

```
10
```

Now we are introducing the other symbol in Jot: `0`. Again if `[F]` represents the value of the program so far, `0` evaluates to `[F]SK`, where `S` and `K` are from [combinatory logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic). I've defined the entire language now.

### Length 5

```
11100
```

I will now prove that Jot is Turing complete by defining a mapping from [combinatory logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) to Jot. This Jot program is the [K combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Examples_of_combinators).

### Length 8

```
11111000
```

This is the S combinator.

### Length 3

```
1AB
```

Here, `A` and `B` are not part of Jot, but rather placeholders for an arbitrary expression. The expression `AB` in combinatory logic maps to `1AB` in Jot, with `A` and `B` recursively transformed by these three rules. QED

### Length N

```
1
10
11
100
101
110
[...]
```

Every natural number, expressed in binary, is a valid Jot program. Consequently, I can algorithmically generate more snippets of arbitrary length. Given enough upvotes, I can solve the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: Two upvotes given. Now define the language.

Comment: @JanDvorak working on it...it's been so long since I researched this thing that I forgot all of it :)

Comment: @PhilFrost There are single combinators which are turing complete by themselves.

Comment: I don't see why this should continue getting more upvotes. You are simply going to generate random binary numbers of increasing length :|

Comment: @Optimizer with 5 votes I can give the next step in the Turing completeness proof.

Comment: You said so for upvote number 4. But here we are looking at a "random number you just generated"

Comment: @proudhaskeller Yes, but combinatory logic requires an infinite set of variables and parenthesis in its syntax. Jot has neither: `1` and `0` are the *only* characters in the language.

Comment: I think you should evaluate all of the programs to the lambda equivalent. Im a bit curious what would the last one be... Also, the first one reduces to the identity function.

Comment: @proudhaskeller I'll give it a try if you promise to check my work.

Comment: @PhilFrost Sure.

Comment: @proudhaskeller I'm pretty sure I've got something wrong, but I'm out of time for this. I've made it community wiki -- if you want to give it a shot feel free.

Comment: how can you solve the halting problem? I'm guessing it has something to do with using an infinite (number of infinite) program?

Answer (score 38):

## Matlab

#### Snippet 26 - iterate over matrices

This is something I just recently discovered. Usually you iterate over a given vector in for loops. But instead of vectors, you can also use matrices (`rand(10)` produces a 10x10 matrix with uniformly distributed numbers between 0 and 1).

```
for k=rand(10);disp(k);end
```

This then displays one column vector of the random matrix per iteration.

#### Snippet 25 - easy plotting

We know plotting is easy in matlab, but there is a super easy function `ezplot` (`E-Z` get it? It took quite a while until I finally got it, as I spelled `Z` always as `sed` instead of `c`, whatever...) Everyone likes elliptic curves:

```
ezplot('y^2-x^3+9*x-10.3')
```

[image: elliptic curve]

#### Snippet 24 - integration

The old fashioned word (but still in use in numerical computation) for integration is 'quadrature', can you guess what the result of the following one is?

```
quad(@(x)4./(1+x.^2),0,1)
```

#### Snippet 23 - images

Of course Matlab is also very popular among scientists who have to work with images (e.g. medical image analysis), so here is a very handy function. First argument is the image, second the angle and the third optional argument here tells the function to crop it to original size.

```
imrotate(rand(99),9,'c')
```

[image: here]

#### Snippet 22 - music

```
load handel;sound(y,Fs)
```

It will sound about like [this (youtube link)](https://www.youtube.com/v/wIIH5Bva738&start=9&end=19&autoplay=1)

#### Snippet 21 - differentiate & integrate

```
polyint(polyder(p),c)
```

You can easily differentiate and integrate polynomials by using those two functions. When integrating, you can pass a second argument that will be the constant.

#### Snippet 20 - back to polynomials

```
p=poly(r);cp=poly(A)
```

Want the polynomial with the roots in `r`? Easy: `p=poly(r)`. Want the characteristic polynomial of a matrix `A`? Easy: `cp=poly(A)`. So `roots(p)` is exactly `r` (or a permutation of `r`).

#### Snippet 19 - another magic trick

```
fminsearch(fun,x0);
```

There are people who absolutely love this function. This basically just searches a minimum of `fun` with an initial value `x0` (can be a vector) without any conditions on `fun`. This is great for fitting small models where you cannot (or you are too lazy) to differentiate the error/penalty/objective function. It uses the [Nelder-Mead simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) which is pretty fast for functions where you cannot make any assumptions.

#### Snippet 18 - intro to polynomials

```
p=polyfit(x,y,deg)
```

Matlab has a nice solution for coping with polynomials. With `polyfit` you get a least squares polynomial of degree `deg` that approximates the points in `x,y`. You get a vector `p` that stores the coefficients of the polynomials, because that is the only thing what you need for representing a polynomial. If you go back to snippet 15, you can do the same thing by writing `c = polyfit(x,y,2)`.  So e.g. `[1,-2,3]` represents the polynomial `x^2 - 2*x+3`.
Of course there are also functions for fitting other elementary, or arbitrary functions.

#### Snippet 17 - angles and discontinuities

```
unwrap(angle(c))
```

If you want to get the argument of a 'continuous' vector of complex numbers you often get back values that seem to have a discontinuity. E.g. `angle([-1-0.2i,-1-0.1i,-1,-1+0.1i,-1+0.2i])` will get you `[-2.94,-3.04,3.14,3.04,2.94]` since `angle` only returns angles between `-pi` and `pi`. The function `unwrap` will take care of this! If you get a discontinuity like this, it will just add a multiple of `2*pi` in order to remove those: '[-2.94,-3.04,-3.14,-3.24,-3.34]' This even works for 2d-matrices! If you just plot the argument of complex numbers with a negative real part you get the first graphics you'll get the first image, with unwrap you get the second one:

[image: without unwrap] [image: with unwrap]

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-1:0.01:0,-0.5:0.01:0.5);
z = x+i*y;
imagesc(angle(z))
imagesc(unwrap(angle(z)))
```

#### Snippet 16 - scalar product

```
[1;2;3]'*[4;5;6]
```

Of course there are built in methods (like `dot`), but with the matrix-transformation operator `'` it is as simple as that. If you do not know whether you have row or column vectors, you can just use `a(:)'*b(:)` where `a(:)` always returns a column vector.

#### Snippet 15 - linear least squares, the ugly method with the magic wand

```
[x.^2,x,x.^0]\y
```

`x` is the (column) vector with the values on the x-axis, `y` the noisy y-values. Type `c=[x.^2,x,x.^0]\y` and you get the coefficients of the 2nd degree polynomial. Of course you can use one of the billion builtin fit functions of matlab (how boring) why not use the magic wand?=)

```
x = (-1:0.1:2)';
y = 3*x.^2-2*x+1+randn(size(x)); %add some gaussian (normal) noise
A = [x.^2,x,x.^0];
c = A\y              %output: c = ]3.0049; -2.3484; 1.1852]
plot(x,y,'x',x,A*c,'-')
```

[image: linreg]

#### Snippet 14 - graphs

```
gplot(graph,x)
```

That is how to plot a graph. `graph` should contain a square adjacency matrix and `x` should be a nx2 matrix that contains the coordinates of each node. Lets make a random graph: `graph = triu( rand(8)>.7)` (make a Matrix that contains 0s and 1s, get only the upper triangle for an interesting graph). `x = rand(8,2)` then plot with some fancy styles `gplot(graph,x,'k-.d')`

[image: graph] (I declare this as modern art.)

#### Snippet 13 - meshgrid

```
meshgrid(a,b)
```

This is one of the most awesomest functions, simple but useful. If you want to plot a real valued function depending on two variables, you can just define a vector of values for the x-axis and one for the y-axis (a and b). Then with meshgrid, you can create two matrices of the size len(a) x len(b) where one has only the vector `a` as column, and the other has only the column has only the vectors `b` as rows. Usage example:`a = -3:0.2:3;[x,y]=meshgrid(a)` (if both vectors are the same, it is sufficient to just pass one.) Then you can just type `z=x.^2+-y.^2` and e.g. `mesh(x,y,z)`. This works for an arbitrary number of dimensions! So this is not only great for plotting, but also for getting all possible combinations of different vectors etc... (So, if you want to create a new code golf language, this should be in there, just make sure you use a shorter function name...)

[image: mesh]

#### Snippet 12 - plotting

```
plot(x,x.^2)
```

Take a vector `x=-3:0.5:3` and and let `plot` do the rest. There are many more functions for plotting this is just a very basic one that you can use all the time. It would be already enough to write `plot(v)` and the data in `v` will be plotted against the array indices. How simple is that? If you want to style your plot, just add a string as a third argument: e.g. `'r:o'` will make a red, dotted line with circles around the data points. If you want multiple plots, just add more arguments, or use matrices instead of vectors. Foolproof. [image: plot]

#### Snippet 11 - function handles

```
f=@(x,y)x+y
```

This is an example of a function handle that gets stored in `f`. Now you can call `f(1,2)` and get `3`. Function handles in matlab are very useful for math functions (e.g. plotting) and you can define them in one line. But one drawback is that you cannot have conditionals or piecewise (and therefore no recursion). If you want this, you have to use the `function` statement and declare a new function, and each of those has to be stored in a separate file... (WHYYYYYY????)

PS: You'll get another funny easter egg if you type `why` in the console: They made a huge function that produces random messages like:

```
The tall system manager obeyed some engineer.
The programmer suggested it.
It's your karma.
A tall and good and not excessively rich and bald and very smart and good tall and tall and terrified and rich and not very terrified and smart and tall and young hamster insisted on it.
```

...which is very comforting if you are desperate enough to ask the console `why`...

#### Snippet 10 - How does my matrix look?

```
spy(eye(9))
```

As you know by now `eye(9)` creates a 9x9 identity matrix. `spy` just creates a that shows the zero/nonzero entries of the matrix. But you can also use it for displaying any binary 2d data. If you call `spy` without argument you'll get a nice little easter egg=)

[image: spy on identity] [image: spy easteregg]

#### Snippet 9

```
kron(a,b)
```

The `kron` function evaluates the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of two matrices. This is very useful for discretisized multidimensional linear operators. I also used it every now and then for code golfing. You want all possible products of the entries of `a` and `b`? `kron(a,b)`, here you go.

#### Snippet 8

```
5*a\b.*b
```

Ok here I mixed up 3 different operator. You can multiply any matrix by a scalar by just using `*`. (Then every entry of the matrix gets multiplied by that scalar). But `*` also performs matrix multiplications. If you prepend a dot you get the `.*` operator, this one multiplies two matrices of the same size but *entry wise*. (This can also be done with division operators like `/` and `\`.)

Next, the backslash operator can be used as left division (in contrast to `/` which performs right division as you are used to) but it is also the most powerful and characteristic operator of matlab: It performs a 'matrix division'. Lets say you have the system of linear equations `A*x=b` and you want to solve it for `x`, then you can just type `x=A\b`. And `\` (you can also use `/` but that is less common for matrices) first quickly analyzes the matrix, and uses the results to find the fastest algorithm to perform this inversion-multiplication! (See e.g. [here](//stackoverflow.com/q/18553210))

But you can also use it for under- or over-defined systems (where the there exists no inverse or where the matrix isn't even square, e.g. for least squares method). This really is **the magic wand** of matlab.

#### Snippet 7

```
[a,b;c]
```

Ok that does not look like much, but it is a very convenient tool: Matrix concatenation. A comma between two expressions means that they get concatenated horizontally (that means they have to have the same height) and a semicolon means that the previous 'line' will be above the next 'line' (by line I mean everything between two semicolons. Just a simple example:  `a = [1,2;3,4]; b = [5;6]; c =[7,8,9]; d=[a,b;c];` will result in the same `d` as `d=[1,2,5; 3,5,6; 7,8,9]`. (Get it?)

#### Snipped 6

```
eye(7)
```

This function produces a full 7x7 identity matrix. It is that easy. There are other functions like `nan,inf,ones,zeros,rand,randi,randn` that work the very same way. (If you pass two arguments you can set the height/width of the resulting matrix.) As I will show later, you can easily create and (and in a very visual way) concatenate matrices (2d-arrays) which is sooo damn useful and easy if you have to numerically solve partial differential equations. (When you solve PDEs the general approach is discretisizig the derivative operators, basically you will get just a huge system of linear equations that needs to be solved. These matrices normally are sparse (only very few non-zero elements) and have some kind of symmetry. That's why you can easily 'compose' the matrix you need.

#### Snippet 5

```
a(a>0.5)
```

I hope you are not getting tired by all the ways of accessing arrays. This shows an easy way to get all elements of an array that meet some conditions. In this case you get a vector of all elements of `a` that are greater than 0.5. The expression `a>0.5` just returns a matrix of the same size as `a` with ones for each element that satisfies the condition and a `0` for each element that doesn't.

#### Snippet 4

```
a(:)
```

This again just returns the contents of `a` as a column vector (nx1 matrix). This is nice if you do not know whether you stored your data as column or row vector, or if your data is two dimensional (e.g. for 2d finite differences methods).

#### Snippet 3

```
1:9
```

You can easily make vectors (in this case 1xn matrices) with the semicolon operator. In this case you get the vector `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. This is also particularly nice for accessing slices of other vectors as e.g. `a(2:4)` accesses the second, third and fourth element of the vector `a`. You can also use it with a step size, like `0:0.5:10` or so.

#### Snippet 2

```
i;
```

A semicolon suppresses output to console. You can see it as a good or a bad thing, but I like it for debugging stuff. Any line of calculation etc. will automatically print its result to the console, as long as you do not suppress the output by a semicolon.

#### Snippet 1

```
i
```

Complex number are a basic number type. (Too bad many people use `i` as a counting variable in for loops in which case it gets overridden.)

#### Intro

For those who do not know, MatLab is a programming language (with nice IDE that is also called MatLab?) that is first of all intended for numerical calculations* and data manipulation. (There is an open source counterpart called "Octave") As it is only** interpreted it is not very fast, but it's strength are that you can easily manipulate matrices and many algorithms are implemented in an optimized way such that they run pretty fast when applied on matrices. It also is a very easy language to learn, but I do not recommend it as a starter language as you will assume pretty bad 'programming' habits.

*As it is a interpreted language it can be very slow for expensive projects, but you have built-in parallelization methods, and you can also use multiple computers together to run a program. But if you really wanna get fast I think you still depend on C or Fortran or crazy stuff like that. But still many implemented algorithms (matrix multiplication, solving systems of linear equations etc) are heavily optimized and perform quite well. But if you program the same algorithms in Matlab itself, you're gonna have to wait=) (Something really unintuitive when you come from other languages is that if you vectorize your operations instead of using for loops, you can save much time in Matlab.)

**You can sort of compile your programs, but that mainly converts the source code to an unreadable file (for humans), that is not that much faster when executed.

Comment: I have this problem very often...setting `i` to something and then experiencing unexpected behavior when it is not the complex unit.

Comment: I tried to upvote but the unmatched asterisks in the Intro are preventing me :)

Comment: Oh I totally forgot about those=) Gonna complete these right now.

Comment: Nice easter egg! If you type 'edit spy' you find an example of code obfuscation :-)

Comment: I went to upvote this and then realized I already had. Alas, if only I could upvote it again. Keep 'em coming, @flawr!

Comment: The introduction is a bit out of date. Since Matlab does have Just In Time execution in recent versions, it has become quite straightforward to write code (with loops) that has similar runtimes as C++ for example. (Perhaps plus a few %)

Comment: I think this sentence isn't right, not sure what is should be: (you can also use \ but that is less common for matrices). Nice answer overall, look forward to seeing it grow.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Thanks, that should have been a `/`! Well what I've written is generally what I've heard so far, I have no experience when it comes to comparing with C++ etc (and I am using a 2009 version=). But I am running out of ideas now =/

Comment: If you are running out of inspiration on things to show, I can recommend the [Mathworks blog: On the Art of MATLAB by Loren Vershure](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/) Often they describe best practices that can be shown within the character limit. For curiosities consider [Abandon Matlab](https://abandonmatlab.wordpress.com/), and for undocumented functions and features you can go to [Undocumented Matlab by Yair Altman](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/category/undocumented-function)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Oh thanks, I was not aware of thos websites, let's have a look=)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: Abandon Matlab is hilarious.

Comment: @flawr: Here's a suggestion for snippet 22: filter([0.5,0.5],.9,x) takes time series vector x and applies a moving average filter of window length two.

Comment: @flawr - For the factoid, it may also be cool to mention the fact that historically, MATLAB was originally created for the students in Computer Science at the University of New Mexico (Cleve Moler was chairman at the time) as an easy interface to the [LINPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINPACK) and [EISPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EISPACK) (... now being superseded by [LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK)) without having to learn FORTRAN.... and because of its ease of use, it spread to other academic institutions very quickly :)

Answer (score 38):

## Bash

#### Factoid:

The extremely serious ShellShock bug was present in Bash since 1989, and remained undiscovered for a quarter of a century.  Much of the joy of writing Bash is coming to grips with its many idiosyncracies and inconsistencies.

#### Length 1 snippet:

```bash
[
```

An alias for the `test` builtin, allowing code of the format `if [ a == b ]; then` - in reality `[` is a standalone command, not a syntactical element, and `]` is purely decorative (although required by [, its requirement is arbitrary and you can do away with it by using `alias [=test`).

#### Length 2 snippet:

```bash
||
```

Like logical `or` in most languages, but for processes.  Will execute the command after the `||` only if the command before it returns non-zero.

#### Length 3 snippet:

```bash
x=y
```

Assignment.  Nice and predictable... but unlike most other languages, extra spaces aren't allowed. Which is kind of funny because you can stick extra spaces pretty much everywhere else between things in bash, just not around the `=`.

#### Length 4 snippet:

```bash
$IFS
```

**Internal Field Separator** - this variable affects how Bash splits data for many built-in actions, such as iterating in for loops and populating arrays from strings.  Used correctly it can be very powerful; but more often it's the cause of subtle and unpredictable bugs.

#### Length 5 snippet:

```bash
${x^}
```

Substitute the string in x, but with the first character capitalised!  Such a frequently used feature that it has its own dedicated piece of language syntax.

#### Length 6 snippet:

```bash
x=($y)
```

Fill an array, x, from a string or list of elements y, splitting on whatever the IFS is currently set to - by default, whitespace.  A very useful feature for advanced bash programming.

#### Length 7 snippet:

```bash
${x[y]}
```

Arrays!  But wait, what's that... y is a string, not a numerical index?  Yes indeed, Bash supports associative arrays!  Many people don't know this.  You just need to `declare -A x` first.

#### Length 8 snippet:

```bash
${x##*,}
```

Substitute x, everything up until the last `,` character (or whatever you specify).  Useful to get the last field of a csv - this is something you can't so easily do with `cut`, which only counts fields from the left.  % and %% allows the same to cut from the right; % and # were chosen for their location on the US keyboard so it would be clear which means left and which means right, but that doesn't hold much value for everyone not using a US keyboard :)

#### Length 9 snippet:

```bash
[ a = b ]
```

In most other languages, a single equals in a comparison operation would produce unintended behaviour in the form of an assignment.  Not in Bash, though.  Just don't omit any of the spaces, whatever you do!

#### Length 10 snippet:

```bash
if [ a=b ]
```

This is what happens if you forget about the mandatory spaces.  Will not throw an error.  **Will always return true** - even if `a` and `b` are variables that are unset, or whatever they're set to, doesn't matter - it'll always return true.  Think about code like `if [ "$password"="$correctpass" ]` to see the fun potential of this "feature".

#### Length 11 snippet:

```bash
x=${y//a/b}
```

Regex-style substring replacement!  Set x to the value of y but with every instance of a replaced with b.

#### Length 12 snippet:

```bash
[[:upper:]]*
```

Pattern matching - you aren't limited to just using the * wildcard in the shell, you can use any POSIX standard match such as `alnum`, `alpha`, `digit` etc.

#### Length 13 snippet:

```bash
function x(){
```

A bit of C syntax has mysteriously crept in!  One of many completely different uses for curly braces, and another example of optional decorative elements to make Bash look more like other languages - either `()` or `function` can be omitted here (but not both).  Also more fun with inconsistent spaces - a space after the `{` is mandatory, but **not** before the closing `}`, as in `function x { y;}`

#### Length 14 snippet:

```bash
echo {Z..A..3}
```

Yet another totally unrelated use of curly braces. Expands a range with a specified step.  In this case, will produce every 3rd letter from Z to A.  Useful for generating sequences without using seq, but cannot be used with variables, so has limited functionality.

#### Length 15 snippet:

```bash
echo {a,b,c,d}x
```

Another similar but not identical use for curly braces in sequence generation; prints `ax bx cx dx`, and is useful for generating a list of strings from a sequence or list in a single command.  Again however, limited in usefulness as it can't be used with variables inside the braces.

Comment: Actually, `]` is not purely decorative. `[` will refuse to function if its last argument isn't `]`.

Comment: Yes, but it serves no purpose other than cosmetics; and if you substitute ```[``` with its other form ```test```, then the ```]``` can be omitted without changing anything else in the call - I'm simply making the point that it's not actual bash syntax, just visual sugar.

Comment: You're right in that it's not bash syntax, but the trailing `]` is `[` syntax and you have to provide it just like how you have to terminate a statement in C with a semicolon.

Comment: It's true that it's mandatory, but not at all in the same way as the C semicolon.  The requirement for it is entirely arbitrary, as seen if you simply ```alias [=test``` and then write ```if [ 1 = 1; then``` etc.  But I'll clarify my wording to take your point into account :)

Comment: Regarding the `function x(){` syntax: You can drop the parens, as you say, but you can also just drop the `function` part. In fact, that's how POSIX shell defines functions, so it's more portable that way. You could define a full function in 13 characters. For example: `x(){ startx;}`

Comment: @kojiro Yes, very good point :)  I'll edit to mention that "function" is also optional.

Comment: If you run `alias [=test` then while `[ 1 = 1` works, `[ 1 = 1 ]` will complain `bash: test: too many arguments`. I don't suggest breaking things that might load later, which means you'd want something like `test2(){ local x=;for i in "$@";do test -z "$x"&&x=1&&set --;test "$i" != \]&&set -- "$@" "$i";done;test "$@";};alias [=test2` — though this seems pedantic and against the spirit of the language. I do not recommend it.

Answer (score 35):

## Common Lisp

Lisp (from LISt Processing) is one of the oldest languages still in use today (only FORTRAN is older). It is notable for being the first language where code is data and data is code; called homoiconicity. It was also the first language to have garbage collection. Originally designed by John McCarthy in a 1958 paper as an entirely theoretical language, it became a real language when Steve Russel realized that the eval function could be implemented on a computer. It's most prevalent in Artificial Intelligence, and is instantly recognizable from its preponderance of parentheses. Common Lisp was designed to unify many of the older Lisp dialects into a more standardized form.

I'll be trying for every snippet to be runnable on it's own, though not necessarily do anything of value. Additionally, because I'm using Common Lisp, the fundamental concepts and a lot of the syntax apply in other dialects, but certain functions won't work in, say, Scheme.

#### Length 1

```
*
```

Because of the emphasis on the use of S-Expressions and lists for coding, there're very few valid expressions in Lisp that don't contain parentheses, called atoms. Anything typed directly into the REPL (read-eval-print loop) is treated as a variable and evaluated as such. `*` holds the previous value that was printed by the REPL.

#### Length 2

```
()
```

This is the empty list, one of the most important symbols in Lisp. Every proper list in Lisp is terminated with an empty list, similar to how every proper string in C ends with `\0`.

#### Length 3

```
(*)
```

This is a basic function call, which consists of a symbol wrapped in parentheses. Lisp doesn't contain operators, they're just functions too. I picked multiplication specifically because it's not actually a binary function; the multiplication operator in Lisp takes an indefinite number of arguments. If it is given no arguments it returns `1`, the identity operator for multiplication.

#### Length 4

```
`(1)
```

This is a cons cell, which is just another way of saying it's a pair of elements. In Lisp, each list consists of cons cells connected to cons cells, where the first element (the `car`) is the value and the second element (the `cdr`) points to the next cons cell. This forms the basis of Lisp being based upon linked lists. This particular cons cell has `1` as the car and the empty list as its cdr.

#### Length 7

```
(not t)
```

I want to touch on truth values in Lisp. This would return `nil`. In Common Lisp, `t` is the symbol for true while `nil` and `()` represent false and are equal to each other, but note that this definition isn't standard for all Lisp dialects; Scheme, for example, distinguishes between `#f` for false and `'()` for the empty list.

#### Length 9

```
(cdr ())
```

As I said before, the cdr is the tail element of a list, which you can get with the function `cdr`. Likewise, you can get the head element, the car, with the function `car`. Pretty simple, right? The car and cdr of the empty list are both `nil`.

#### Length 10

```
(cons 1 2)
```

Finally, enough length to start working with lists. `cons` creates a cons cell with the first parameter as the car and the second as the cdr. But instead of printing out `(1 2)`, it gives `(1 . 2)`. Going back to the length 2 snippet, a proper list is supposed to end with the empty list, so the cdr of the last cons cell should point to the empty list. In this case, the last cons cell points to `2`, so Lisp informs us that we have an improper list, but still allows us to do it, like how you can make a C-string without a `\0`.

#### Length 11

```
(cons 1 ())
```

Now we have created our first properly formed list. It's a single cons cell with a car of `1` and a cdr of `()`. You'll notice that for every other list, I lead it with a backquote/tick; any other proper list would attempt to evaluate its first argument as a function with the remaining elements as parameters. Strictly speaking, `()` isn't a list though; it's a symbol composed of a `(` and a `)` that represents the empty list. Lisp allows you to use almost any printable character in a symbol name and will let you redefine any symbol as you want to.

#### Length 12

```
(cdr `(1 2))
```

This would output `(2)`, not `2` as some people would guess. Remember, each cdr is supposed to point to either another cons cell or the empty list; obviously `2` isn't the empty list, so it must be another cons cell the a car of `2` and a cdr of `()`.

#### Length 13

```
'#1=(1 . #1#)
```

This would produce a circular list with just the single value 1. If printed, it would print “(1 1 1 1 ...” forever, so that in practice it can be considered an infinite list (on which you can do `cdr` infinite times to obtain always the same result, itself!). Unless one assigns `T` to the global variable `*print-circle*`, in which case it will be printed as `#1=(1 . #1#)`.

Comment: That last edit! Quick, someone make an Beatles-themed esolang:D

Comment: @fedes. John McCarthy, Paul McCartney... the language shall be called CarthyCartney.

Answer (score 34):

## CJam

[Try the below snippets here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

**Length 20 snippet:**

```
q~{]__~z\z<=\~*0>*}*
```

[A min-mod calculator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42081/31414). An excerpt from the question :

> The **minmod** function is a variant of the familiar **min**, which appears in slope-limiting high-resolution schemes for partial differential equations. Given a number of slopes, it picks out the flattest slope, while taking care of relative signs between the slopes.
>
> The function takes an arbitrary number of parameters. Then *minmod(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>)* is defined as:
>
> - *min(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>)*, if all x<sub>i</sub> are strictly positive
> - *max(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>)*, if all x<sub>i</sub> are strictly negative
> - *0*, otherwise.

**Length 18 snippet:**

```
l'[,65>Dm>_el+_$er
```

A ROT13 encoder. Shifts only `a-zA-Z` characters from the input string via STDIN

**Length 15 snippet:**

```
T1{_2$+}ri2-*]p
```

A full program to print the first `N` numbers from a Fibonacci series where `N` is provided as an input via STDIN.

**Length 12 snippet:**

```
{{_@\%}h;}:G
```

A simple GCD function. This can be used like `2706 410 G` to get the GCD on stack.

**Length 11 snippet:**

```
123456 789#
```

`#` is the power operator. This snippet shows a cool feature of CJam that it supports BigInts for almost all mathematical operations. So the output of the above code is

```
1596346205622537943703716803040694151242100030904924074732295184521676912291137885341977590649991707684635184329980991487148618486236239062505001539322685142817506810040361209550544146292158784625519911512640361780862459268161619223326802388689703997604303632605734938879647069477372395799326590488746599202521617640394227957532720581758771344616555153473551874187964029973716015080326283503474062024803237072761129557356772954771383125420283743787215768524095651476398918270831514362626616089349128838080859262141293069421199363839940462244772673481244848208112002212957221705577938865719802035511067875502253218277834350725436729497351901219311577128600087062378434520948898301738545267825952998284599001356281260973911216650526574435975050678439968995805415462116669892745933523276658479456263859786003695570642598885206779863730608803831608206418317758451327165760242416052588688579435998154295782751455020445483571514197850814391880423853968520336337963918534259580183058727377932419280412466915889059399591196961188841001024998633317094826403760131868252088477018937989608302521450181593409274231460335072324865982559395114735391976545471553525054490202974741119144469523879456646833238659929705233941114530149037245274032070536718197592615630616792756562341411027203615235147973615347081993563361626845258162606172599728677944001956482301240050182368840648532697569098833480384074404562991348377266778603059081932412368912313845464302833428950934701568958836851009236647605585910687215977468114323293396641238344799575626940766355697576957869656153567798618227770961980620119004224798449940378878601283741944503399682599666873704888519152796472231721010884561046439019823540214190109829183178504573391524533915085342799888899681052113605127068137552531204917650779012455136663716975904242872042805633443567570913936237754642040107392687168596924804730637819953463737212774674563401663682370631910559669378413063684132477269578881395521544729393136204246705936061735379354437327940116154383441927197123218522827575163913310005036963663583344508839784971260123709283218409462028161021477446586507813599051643059982983426688872855309396405653159417356549291603532443699350168178837164682957610433456205211423600319694496115159970718912091395232327389520091646132878609779171226748990343349416763319432268713023302555895744813731889452605219001900815755497209921418814092923394321459962373890912709775151652200071533644718727513889263907829300496554849544461628702471995210369421320165755673222520834013956492183306187393652197405863508709529644837118590847002900783148394313160749018413291215958936871830666201928218294362550829287373305552379418641499562597137520153409556227576809855521876196531587454478159211299517511047868125975115347272184123454929507976958328038242400918390689757262398695703472270927183494613959476164389143107240083171566284628032072645081703351075328092783401422849512230275075331561337345714881104575020436358133210849231625973013523497330004645467493618279226202227586584610761439335895760888873155403816627190368675397978355381544497413492223577022267403347927237298551052219150516984577176643706356698282552857754120841266435149587248192704898338826251727748499150285409036076919533685800933215325289882260771526293167171975367192287689881199864600661035143522211647660445960687046757311913589429739868592726372013684511683081229044622752191694278221303073075505531920922815724661725685493922212700535444400760813940151761980008355835574184921854364539924999643954874549857103642483664109073938527328920827803218865362851320233433429604394590974694396314165313743853607609394553133883545319222169958204731303672940856293527174545435349105954532301106962634516087237739490953930886293289854731305112253177512851251930821765454042415085420000484369355605183062368648992392499663861508991984554431113080399485470268940148600970493633737364443822752829774334511729579419931500217970224646496435527826186627011323464848141074486509849545954714213290443775688291020289759390171236344528896
```

**Length 10 snippet:**

```
"`%W_"_W%`
```

We've already done quine, lets reverse it!. This is one of the shortest reverse quine in CJam. Reverse quine is a quine which prints its sources code in reverse order.

**Length 9 snippet:**

```
5,K,+_&S*
```

This snippet showcases a lot of features of CJam,

```
5, "create an array of numbers 0 to 4"
K, "create an array of numbers 0 to 19"
+  "List concatination"
_  "Duplicate top stack element"
&  "Set distinct operator in this case"
S* "Join array elements with space character"
```

**Length 8 snippet:**

```
"`_~"`_~
```

One of the smallest possible quines in CJam. This is a true quine in a sense that it does not actually read the source code in any manner. (Reading the source code is not even possible in CJam)

**Length 7 snippet:**

```
"AB"_m*
```

`m*` creates all the Cartesian products of the top two stack elements. For instance, the above code will put `["AA" "AB" "BA" "BB"]` on stack, which is the cartesian product of `"AB"` and `"AB"`.

**Length 6 snippet:**

```
"_~"_~
```

A nice looking repeated code. DO NOT run this :) . This representation of code is the basis for the simplest quine in CJam. You put string `"_~"` on stack, make a copy (`_`) and evaluate it. Which in turns does the same thing again (and again ..) until you reach maximum recursion exception.

**Length 5 snippet:**

```
{A}:F
```

This is how a basic function works in CJam, The above expression assigns the code block `{A}` to variable `F`. Now in your code, you can put `F` anywhere to run the code block (and get `10` in this case)

**Length 4 snippet:**

```
"A"~
```

You can evaluate any code block or string or even a single character using `~`. The above expression results to `10`

**Length 3 snippet:**

```
Kmr
```

A typical random number generator from range 0 to `K` i.e. 20.

**Length 2 snippet:**

```
es
```

This gives the current timestamp (milliseconds from the epoch). CJam also has `et` for local time in a more usable format which returns an array comprising of the various parts of the current time ( day, hour etc).

**Length 1 snippet:**

```
A
```

CJam has almost all capital alphabets as predefined variables. `A` is 10, `B` is 11 and till `K` is 20. `P` is `pi (3.141592653589793)`, `N` is new line and [many others](http://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Variables/). These can come very handy when you need initial values in variables, or even when you need two digit number in 1 byte.

**Factoid**

CJam is inspired by GolfScript but builds a lot of features on top of it including support for a network GET call :D

PS: I will try to update the answer every 5 upvotes or every 2 hours (which ever is earlier)

Comment: There are some issues with your ROT13 example :p But I'm impressed with the quine, I think I'll borrow it :)

Comment: @aditsu what is the issue ?

Comment: It changes the case of n-z letters. Also, it has an @ for no reason, you can put the D there instead.

Comment: @aditsu Pretty sure that its a ROT 13 across a-zA-Z range and that is the reason for case change. Can you not read it ? its only your own language :P @ is there for 18 chars I guess :D

Comment: That's not what ROT13 normally does. I don't understand why you're asking if I can read my own language, the issue is not about understanding what the program does, but about the fact that it doesn't do what's expected.

Comment: @aditsu fixed. The fact that you started with "there are some issues" without telling the issue directly :P

Comment: Very nice! And I just wanted to see if you would notice what's wrong.

Comment: @aditsu I had to look up on Wiki about the actual definition :D

Comment: "_~" <(Nice language you got there.)

Answer (score 34):

## GNU Make

I'll go out on a limb on this one.  I think this may well be the first time that `make` has been featured in PPCG.

#### Factoid

[Make may be considered to be a functional language.](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/Computation.html#Makefile-functional)

#### Length 0 snippet

I don't think length 0 snippets are required, but here is one anyway.  I think this might be the most useful of all length 0 programs.  With an empty Makefile (or even no makefile at all), make still has a bunch of built-in rules.  E.g. there are default built-in rules to compile a .c file into a .o or binary, given the .c file exists in the current directory.  So if we do:

```
make hello.o
```

make will find the .c to .o rule and compile hello.c to give hello.o

Similarly if we do:

```
make goodbye
```

If there is a goodbye.c file in the current directory it will be compiled into the goodbye binary.

#### Length 1 Snippet

<kbd>TAB</kbd>

Yes, the TAB character.  While this doesn't do much on its own, it has great significance in Make.  Specifically all recipe lines following a target definition in a rule MUST start with a TAB.  This causes all sorts of frustrations when debugging makefiles when TABs and spaces get mixed up.

#### Length 2 Snippet

```
$@
```

This is an automatic variable for use in recipes.  It will expand to the filename of the target of the rule.  There are [other useful automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).

#### Length 3 Snippet

```
a:=
```

Shortest simply expanded variable assignment.  The variable a is set to "" immediately when the Makefile is first parsed.  If instead we do `a=`, then the assignment is recursively expanded, i.e. expansion is deferred until the time the variable is actually referenced.

#### Length 4 Snippet

```
W:;w
```

Shortest marginally useful complete rule specification.  This defines a target `W` with a rule that simply runs the `w` shell command.  Thus

```
make W
```

is equivalent to:

```
w
```

This is an alternative rule syntax in that the recipe follows the target on the same line separated by a new line.  More commonly the recipe lines immediately follow a separate target line, with <kbd>TAB</kbd> characters starting each recipe line.

#### Length 5 Snippet

```
$(@D)
```

Another automatic variable.  Similar to `$@`, but this expands to the directory portion of path, with the filename and trailing / removed.

Comment: Maybe some string functions like `$(basename )` or `$(patsubst )`? ([eg.](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/master/olmec/makefile))

Answer (score 33):

## Scala

Scala is a JVM-based, statically-typed (mostly), hybrid functional/object-oriented language, with type inference, higher kinded types, and generics.

**Factoid**: Scala started with the man behind Java generics and a lot of the Java compiler, Martin Odersky.

### 1

#### Snippet

`;`

#### Explanation

There isn't much need for semicolons in Scala (unlike its cousin, Java), but they can still be found in some places, such as `for` statements (also known as "`for` comprehensions"). For example:

```
for (i <- 0 to 10;
     a <- 0 to 10
) yield (i, a)
```

Will return a list going something like (0, 0), (0, 1)... (1, 9), (2, 0)... (10, 10).

### 2

#### Snippet

`()`

#### Explanation

Scala's `Unit` type has only one value: `()`. Used like Java or C's `void`. Don't be fooled, though: it's not an empty tuple!
This type is mostly returned from functions with side effects, to distinguish them from the purely functional ones. In Scala, *every* function *must* return a value. If they don't, they implicitly return `()`.

### 3

#### Snippet

`???`

#### Explanation

An operator which just throws NotImplementedError. Luckily, thanks to Scala's powerful type system, it can be put in any unimplemented function and still be typesafe:

```
def notImplemented: Int = ???
def foo: String = ???
```

One of the best parts of Scala is that there's very little baked-in as compiler magic, and you can write most of the builtins yourself. Operators are simply functions with names that contain symbols - `???` itself can be defined as:

```
def ???: Nothing = throw new NotImplementedError("an implementation is missing");
```

### 4

#### Snippet

`None`

#### Explanation

While Scala does have `null` as part of the language (as an unfortunate holdover from Java), it also has a pre-made option type, called `Option[T]`. If an optional value isn't there, its value is `None`. If a value is optional, make it an `Option`, and you won't ever have a `NullPointerException`. You can also implement Option yourself, like so:

```
sealed trait Option[+T]
case class Some[T](value: T) extends Option[T]
case object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

### 5

#### Snippet

`(1,2)`

#### Explanation

A 2-tuple (a pair) of integers, 1 and 2. Especially useful for returning multiple values from functions, as well as pattern matching. Observe:

```
def printPoint(p: (Int, Int)) = p match {
    case (x, y) => println("X coordinate: " + x + ", Y coordinate: " + y)
}
printPoint((1,2))
// prints "X coordinate: 1, Y coordinate: 2"
```

### 6

#### Snippet

`()=>()`

#### Explanation

An anonymous function. As a functional language, Scala has first-class language support for anonymous functions. To dissect this snippet, it's a function which:

`()` - Takes no parameters,

`=>` - And returns...

`()` - Unit!

### 7

#### Snippet

`s""""""`

#### Explanation

The empty string... with a twist. If you begin and end a string with triple-quotes, you can include unescaped characters inside. For example:

```
"""

"""
```

Is equivalent to:

```
"\n"
```

Also, a string beginning with `s` can have interpolated values in it. For example:

```
val num = 10    
val str = s"There are $num nums"
// str == "There are 10 nums"
```

It gets better though: with braces, you can put expressions inside!

```
val str = s"2 + 2 == ${2 + 2}."
// str == "2 + 2 == 4."
```

### 8

#### Snippet

`Future{}`

#### Explanation

**Futures** are things that will happen or be computed... sometime later. Scala has a lot of different models of concurrency that are each useful in their own way (like the Akka framework), and `Future`s are one of them. `Future{}` computes `()`. Pretty useless, but if I have something really expensive to do, like compute 2 + 2 and multiply that by 5, they're pretty handy:

```
Future {2 + 2} map {_ * 5)
```

They're also great for I/O.
Admittedly, you have to do a couple of imports for this, but they're in the standard library.

### 10

#### Snippet

```
type N=Int
```

#### Explanation

This is a type variable called `N`, which refers to the type `Int`. You could now write:

```
val num: N = 1
```

And it would work.

Addendum: I said type "variable", but these can't vary during runtime. You can use these for some nifty type-level programming like the Heterogeneous List, or HList, which is a List that contain several different types of elements while still being typesafe. If you're interested, watch Daniel Spiewak's "High Wizardry in the Land of Scala": http://vimeo.com/28793245.

### 16

#### Snippet

```
implicit val a=1
```

#### Explanation

Have you ever used a heavyweight dependency injection framework like Guice or Spring? If so, you know that dependency injection is (in essence) supplying objects with their dependencies at construction, so that they can stay loosely coupled. The issue with doing this the easy way is that constructor signatures quickly grow out of control when you start to build large dependency graphs. To fix that, you bring in a DI framework, and soon after, your project has 50k lines of XML. :-(

Now for a seemingly unrelated question: have you ever needed to call a series of functions, all sharing a few parameters? Has that ever become so cluttered that you added an extra class, just to put the parameters in one place?

**Implicits** give you a way to inject a value of a particular type in a particular scope into a function call. This way, functions can ask for a value without you needing to explicitly provide it. It's filled in automatically! One of the best parts, and the reason this relates to DI, is that constructors also work with implicits. You can create huge parameter lists in your constructors to keep them loosely coupled, but users of your classes will never have to supply all of the parameters manually (but they can, if they want).

This particular snippet creates an implicit value of type `Int` in the current scope, with the value of `1`. If any function calls require an implicit `Int`, they'll automatically be fed `1`.

### 17

#### Snippet

```scala
({type I[T]=T})#I
```

#### Explanation

This is a type lambda (in this case acting like an identity function for types). It's a combination of a type member (mentioned above) (`type I[T]` declares a type constructor `I` taking a type parameter `T` ), a structural type (everything between the braces denotes a type), and a type projection (`#I` accesses the member `I` of the structural type in braces).

In Scala 3, this can be expressed much more nicely as `[T] =>> T`.

### 18

#### Snippet

```scala
list.reduce(_ ^ _)
```

#### Explanation

Underscores have [various uses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8000903) in Scala. Here, we can use them to define a trivial function more concisely. The `_ ^ _` is really shorthand for `(a, b) => a ^ b`.

The snippet reduces a list of what may be integers by XOR-ing them. `reduce` is just one of the many useful methods in the standard library. There are many others, such as `map`, `heads`, `distinct`, `groupBy`.

Comment: Excellent tips, please keep them coming.

Comment: snippet 17 suggestion: `(x:{def f:T})⇒x.f`. "duck typing". you can have a function receive anything that has a method `f` which returns a `T`. could be used as poor man's polymorphism. if you have classes from 3rd party library, which expose a method `foo: Bar`, and you want to treat these classes the same way you treat your own classes which expose the same API (i.e. `foo:Bar`), but don't have a suitable interface to inherit from, you can use this syntax.

Comment: @giladhoch It's really structural typing, since it's verified at compile time (as long as you compile with scalac)

Answer (score 32):

## Marbelous

### Length 14 snippet

```
}0}1
Mulx
HxHx
```

This snippet shows off some more of Marbelous libraries and introduces a new concept, namely, multi-cell boards. The `Mulx` board takes two marbles as input and outputs 2 marbles. Marbles that enter the leftmost cell of the `Mulx` will correspond to the `}0` devices in that board and the rightmost cell to `}1`. Analogously, the outputs will come out of different cells as well. The width of a board can be calculated as `MAX(1, highest output device + 1, highest input device + 1)` cells that don't correspond to an input device will trash any marble that falls upon them.

### Length 13 snippet

```
7E
??
>Y!!
{0
```

This is a board that will spit out a random printable ascii character on each tick. Marbelous has two ways of generating random values. There is `??` which returns a random value between 0 and the input marble it receives, inclusive, and `?n`: `?0` up to `?Z` respectively. Which act very similar to `??`. We also have `!!` which terminates the board even if not all outputs are filled. Can you figure out how the `?n` devices could be implemented as boards in Marbelous using `??`?

### Length 12 snippet

```
}0}1
Fb//
Dp
```

Here we see a few library functions of Marbelous in action.
`Fb` outputs the nth fibonacci number where n is the input marble. `Dp` prints the input marble to STDOUT as a decimal number. These are both implemented in Marbelous and can be called upon when you check include libraries in [the online interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40073/making-future-posts-runnable-online-with-stack-snippets/40808#40808), for the python interpreter, you have to explicitely include each file. The inplementation of these boards can be found [on github](https://github.com/marbelous-lang). Note that this particular program takes 2 inputs and will call the Fibonacci board two times. Boards that are called are return within one tick of the board that called them.

### Length 11 snippet

```
}0}0
{<{0{>
```

This one needs some explanation. The `}0` devices are imputs, since they have the same number (0), they will contain the same value when this board gets called. The three devices on the lower row are outputs. `{<` outputs to the left of the board, `{0` outputs underneath the first cell of the board and `{>` outputs to the right. Output is only pushed when all distinct output devices are filled. In this case however, the right output device is never reached. The board will exit because of lack of activity and output the two values it has anyway. Can you imagine how one could implement `/\` as a Marbelous board?

### Length 10 snippet

```
..40
FF
\\
```

There's a few things that play an important role in Marbelous here. Firstly, there's addition. If you trace the path of the two marbles on the board, you'll notice that they'll end up on the same cell at the same time. When this happens, they'll be added together. (fun fact: at some point it was considered that instead of being added together, the marbles should form a stack) However, Marbelous is an 8 bit language, So adding a marble to `FF` is equivalent to subtracting 1 from it.

### Length 9 snippet

```
00
\\/\]]
```

This is the shortest way to implement a rudimentary version of cat in Marbelous.
    00
    \/\
Is a loop that puts a `00`value marble on the `]]` device every second tick. This is an STDIN device. When a marble lands on this device, it tries to read the first character from STDIN, if there is one, it gets pushed down (and in this case printed again). If there isn't one, The original amrble gets pushed to the right. (and in this case trashed)

### Length 8 snippet

```
}0
~~
{0
```

This snippet shows a few features. Firstly it takes input through }0. In this case this is the Main Board and this will be replaced by the command line input. You can also call this function, in that case, the argument will be taken instead of the command line input. Then there's `~~`, which is a bitwise not operator. After that, we get to `}0`, If all `}n` devices are filled, these values are returned as the functions return values. (Marbelous supports more than one return value per function)

### Length 7 snippet

```
00
\\/\
```

This is the most compact infinite loop you can create in Marbelous. The `\\` device pushes any marble to the right, `/\` copies a marble and pushes one copy to the left and another to the right. Since the board is only two cells wide, the marble to the right gets trashed though.

### Length 6 snippet

```
46MB75
```

Here's an example of recursion, `MB` (the implicitly named main board gets called on every tick, but not before Printing `Fu` to STDOUT on each call. (Resulting in the following: `FuFuFuFuFuFu...` This obviously overflows the callstack.

### Length 5 snippet

```
2A
++
```

Some arithmetic, The marble with value `2A` falls down on teh first tick and the finds itself on the `++` cell. This is an operator. This particular operator increments any marble that land on it and lets it fall down. The marble now has value `2B` and falls off the board. This prints `+` to STDOUT.

### Length 4 snippet

```
:
24
```

The two interpreters disagree here, I've given the first board of the file a name in this example (The name is an empty string). The python interpreter assumes this is the Main board and calls this board upon running the program (which prints `$`). The javascript interpreter doesn't find the Main Board and thus no entry point. This can be useful when writing a library file for Marbelous.

### Length 3 snippet

```
:Bo
```

This is a named board, with no body, we can call this board by Writing `Bo` in a cell of any board (including `Bo` itself)

### Length 2 snippet

```
3A
```

This code is the body of a 1x1 cell (each cell is two characters wide) board, implicitly named `MB` (for Main Board). It prints the ascii value of the hexadecimal value of `3A` when the marble falls off the board. The output of this program just so happens to be the source code of:

### Length 1 snippet

```
:
```

Along with `#`, this is one of the two the only valid 1 character programs in marbelous. `#` is an indicator of a comment an therefor not very interesting. `:` tells marbelous that you're about to declare a board. Neither of teh two compilers care that you don't actually name or define the board. The program doesn't do anything.

### factoid:

Marbelous was developed by people on this site, some names that were in the running for this language were *Rube* and simply *Marbles*.

Comment: beat me to it. nice snippets!

Comment: your length 12 snippet seems to take two inputs, and print out two different fibonacci numbers. was that intentional?

Comment: @Sparr, yes it was to showcase how functions work in Marbelous a bit.

Comment: maybe add that to the explanation? from what you wrote, I'd expect the snippet to take one input and output one fib number.

Comment: I really hope you get to 40 points so my fibonacci function will fit...

Comment: If you mark this as community wiki, I'd be happy to keep updating it.

Answer (score 32):

## Pyth

For further snippets, I'll be posting solutions to golf challenges and a link to the problem.

#### Length 17:

```
<ussC,cG\_GUQ*zQQ
```

Find the first `n` characters of the infinite sequence formed by repeating the input string forever, then filling in its underscores with the sequence itself, then repeating that forever.

[Fill In the Blanks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/45264/fill-in-the-blanks)

#### Length 14:

```
#QX=Qhf>FT.:Q2
```

Given a list of unique elements, sort the list by swapping pairs of neighboring elements, printing out all intermediate results.

[Rearranging a set of numbers into order](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49935/rearranging-a-set-of-numbers-into-order)

#### Length 13:

```
?hu]+HG_UQYQY
```

Create the following structure: `[0, [1, [2, [3]]]]`.

[Home on the Range of Lists](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/home-on-the-range-of-lists)

#### Length 12:

```
uxyG*HQjvz2Z
```

XOR multiplication.

[XOR multiplication](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50240/xor-multiplication)

#### Length 11:

```
lfqSzST.:wz
```

Count how many substrings of the first word are anagrams of the second word.

[Detecting anagrams within a Parent String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50250/detecting-anagrams-within-a-parent-string)

#### Length 9:

```
fqJjQT_J2
```

Find the lowest base in which the input is a palindrome.

[Lowest-Base Palindrome](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28404/lowest-base-palindrome)

#### Length 5:

```
!%lQ1
```

Check whether the input is a power of 2. Take the log base 2, take the result mod 1, and take the logical not.

[Check whether an integer is a power of 2 without using +,- operations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17456/check-whether-an-integer-is-a-power-of-2-without-using-operations)

#### Length 4:

```
sjQ2
```

Calculates the hamming weight of the input by adding up the base 2 representation of the input.

[Count the number of ones in unsigned 16 bit integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47870/count-the-number-of-ones-in-unsigned-16-bit-integer)

#### Length 3:

```
^G2
```

`^` on sequence, int, gives the cartesian product of the first argument with itself n times, where n is the second argument.

In this case, since `G` is the alphabet (`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`), `^G2` gives all 2 letter strings, `aa` through `zz`.

#### Length 2:

```
lT
```

`l`, while normaly serving as `len()`, can also be used as log base 2. Since `T` is the variable initialized to `10`, this prints `3.3219280948873626`, log base 2 of 10.

#### Length 1:

```
H
```

`H` is the empty dictionary (hash-table) in Pyth, and is the only way to get a dictionary in Pyth, short of using `v` (eval) or `$` (Python literal).

#### Factoid:

Pyth has no multi-character constructs other than literals. Also, Pyth compiles essentially one-to-one into Python.

Comment: Was your factoid added before you have commands that start with `.`?

Comment: @LeakyNun Yes..

Answer (score 32):

## Forth

Forth has only two types, ints and floats (and the floats are optional!) but it still manages to have chars, strings, long long ints, pointers, function pointers, structs, and more; it's all in how you use it!

### Length 1

`.`

The `.` command (or "word" as we call it) prints out the integer value on top of the data stack; if the stack is empty, you get a runtime error.  It also remove the value from the stack — upvote to see how we can keep it!

### Length 2

`.s`

The `.s` word displays the values currently on the stack, without removing any of them.  It also displays the total number of values.  In Gforth, `.s` is limited by default to only showing the top 9 values; maybe we'll find out how to show more?

### Length 3

`see`

Type `see` followed by any Forth word to see that word's source code.  Most Forth words are defined in Forth itself, and only a few primitives are defined in assembly.

### Length 4

`1 0=`

Did I mention that Forth is a stack-based language with postfix operators?  Typing `1 0=` pushes `1` onto the stack and then executes the `0=` word, which pops the top value off the stack and pushes `true` if it equals 0, `false` if it doesn't.  `0=` is a convenience word for `0 =`; there are several shorthand words like it for common value+word combinations, like `1+` and `0<>`.  Moreover, while `false` in Forth is 0 and any nonzero value is true, the built-in test words return `true` for true results, and `true` goes all the way — it's the value with all bits set, i.e., `-1`!

### Length 5

`-1 u.`

Push `-1` onto the stack, then pop it off and print it as an unsigned integer.  This can be used to quickly see the maximum value for an unsigned int on your version of Forth (but not the maximum integral value that it natively supports!).  You may be asking, "How do we know when an int should be printed with `.` and when with `u.`?"  Answer: `.` when it's signed, `u.` when unsigned.  "That's not what I meant," you say.  "How do we know when the value on top of the stack is signed and when it's unsigned?"  Answer: You're the programmer — that's your job!  You have to know whether each integer on the stack represents an int, an unsigned int, an `int*`, a `char*`, a function pointer, or other, or else you get the demons in your nose.  Forth's not going to keep track of that for you; what is this, C?

### Length 6

`." Hi"`

Prints `Hi`.  `."` is a Forth word (which, like all Forth words, must be followed by whitespace or EOF) that reads the input stream up through the next `"` and prints out any bytes in between.  If you put more than one space after the `."`, all but the space immediately after the `."` will be printed.  Escape sequences are not supported (so you can't print a string with a `"` in it with `."`), but Gforth adds [`.\"`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Displaying-characters-and-strings.html#index-g_t_002e_005c_0022-_0040var_007b-compilation-_0027ccc_0022_0027-_002d_002d-_003b-run_002dtime-_002d_002d---_007d--gforth-2013) to the language, which does support them.

### Length 7

`: + - ;`

You define your own words in Forth by writing a colon, the name of the word, the words that you want your word to execute, and a semicolon.  A word can be any sequence of non-whitespace characters (whitespace is how Forth tells where one word ends and another begins, after all), even punctuation, and even operators (which are just words, after all).  The above snippet redefines `+` to mean `-`, so now whenever you try to add, you subtract instead.  Any pre-existing words that use `+` are unaffected, as they store a reference to the original definition of `+`.

Note: Some words do different things inside definitions of other words than they do outside, but other than control structures, they're all pretty esoteric.  Most words do the same thing inside a definition as outside, but sometimes that thing isn't obvious — `: show-see see see ;` won't do what you think!

### Length 8

`: 42 - ;`

When I said a word could be any sequence of whitespace characters, I meant *any* sequence.  No, Forth does not have a word for each individual number; numbers are just a little special.  When Forth encounters a non-whitespace sequence, it first sees if it's a known word; if it's not, it tries to parse it as a number; if that fails, only then do you get an error.  Defining a word that's spelled the same as a number means that you won't be able to enter that spelling of the number directly anymore without getting the word instead, but [Gforth and various other Forths give you multiple ways to spell numbers anyway](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Number-Conversion.html).

### Length 9

`IF 1 THEN`

*Finally*, something familiar!  Obviously, this code tests whether its argument `1` is true and, if so, executes whatever's after the `THEN`, right?  Wrong.  When execution reaches the `IF`, the value on top of the stack is popped off, and if *that* value is true (i.e., nonzero), execution continues with whatever's inside the `IF ... THEN` and then whatever's after the `THEN`; if the value is zero, we just skip straight to after `THEN`.  Note that, due to how these words are implemented internally (which is in terms of other Forth words!), `IF` and `THEN` can only be used inside a word definition, not in "interpret state."

### Length 12

`( x y -- y )`

This is a comment.  It goes from the `(` to the next `)` immediately after it.  (In the interpreter, a newline can also end it.)  This is not "built in" to Forth's syntax (Is anything?); `(` is just another word, one that discards everything in the input stream up through the next `)`.  (That's right — Forth can manipulate how its source code is read.  Perl's not the only language that can't be parsed without executing it!)  Since it's a word, you have to follow it with a space, or else Forth will complain that `(x` is undefined.  We can also redefine `(` as part of our ongoing campaign of shooting ourselves in the foot.

The comment's content is more interesting, however.  This comment specifices the *stack effect* for some word; the part to the left of the `--` lists what should be on the top of the stack before you run the word (the top is on the right), and the right side of the `--` describes what the top of the stack will look like afterwards (again, the top is on the right).  Common convention is to add such a comment to the source of any word you define, right after the `: name` bit, and there is also a very strong convention about [naming stack elements to indicate their type](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Notation.html#index-types-of-stack-items-171) that is even followed by [the standard](https://www.taygeta.com/forth/dpans.html).

Incidentally, the stack effect shown is for the `nip` word.  You should be able to tell what it does just from the comment.

### Length 13

`1 2 3 4 d+ d.`

As previously indicated, a Forth value's type is all in how you use it — if you treat a value as a pointer, it's a pointer, and if that value's not a *good* pointer, it's your fault for treating it as one.  However, regardless of what type you're treating a value as, it will always take up one cell on the data stack; the exceptions are *double cell* or *double precision integers*.  These are integers that are represented by two values on the stack, allowing you to perform arithmetic with twice as many bits as usual.  The more significant or higher-bit cell is placed on top of the less significant or lower-bit one, so that `1 0` is the double cell representation of `1`, and `0 1` is either 2^32 or 2^64, depending on how big your Forth's regular cells are.  Naturally, in order to treat a double-cell value as such, we need to use words that explicitly operate on double-cell values; these are generally just `d` (or `ud` for unsigned) followed by the name of the corresponding single-cell word: `d+` for addition, `d<` for comparison, `d.` for printing, etc.

Comment: +1 for Forth. I was starting to look for languages that hadn't been done yet. Happy to see it here already.

Comment: Also, if you ever get to +1675, I've got a nice ASCII image to output. :D

Answer (score 32):

## [Ruby](http://ruby-lang.org/)

Ruby is a dynamic, reflective, object-oriented, general-purpose programming language. It was designed and developed in the mid-1990s by Yukihiro "Matz" Matsumoto in Japan.

[Link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/44803/edit) for myself, or anyone who wants to contribute to this answer.

**Length 19 (by a guest)**

```
[1, 2].each{|i|p i}
```

Ruby supports `for` loops, but the `.each` method is preferred. The code in brackets is a **block**, essentially a single-use anonymous function. Blocks can take parameters, which are enclosed in pipe characters. The `p` is a shortcut for `puts [something].inspect`. The `.inspect` method is a variation of `.to_s` which provides more details about the object.

**Length 18**

```
%i[I love you too]
```

This is an example on how to create an array of symbols, the result would be: `[:I, :love, :you, :too]`

**Length 17**

```
'1.34'[/(\.\d+)/]
```

This is an example on creating snippet then parse it using [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). This regular expression means get any dot `\.` that followed by one or more (`+`) digit (`\d`) then capture it. The result of this snippet is a new string containing `.34`.

**Length 16**

```
'abcdefg'[3..-1]
```

This statement means, create a string containing `abcdefg`, then get the fourth (4th = `3`) character until the end (last = `-1`). Another example: `[3..3]` get the fourth character only (`d`), `[3..5]` get the fourth until sixth characters (`def`), `[-3..-1]` get the third last character until the last character (`efg`).

**Length 15**

```
%w{i love you!}
```

This is a shortcut to create array of words (`string`), that is equal to `['i', 'love', 'you!']`

**Length 14**

```
[1,2,3,4]*'ab'
```

Array multiplication with a string equals to call a `.join` method, the result of this snippet is `1ab2ab3ab4`, that also equal to calling: `[1,2,3,4].join 'ab'`

**Length 13**

```
y=->x{x**3}
```

This is an example on how to create a [`lambda`](http://pragdave.me/blog/2008/05/22/new-lambda-syntax-in-ruby-19/) (or sometimes called anonymous function) using stab operator `->`. This statement means create an anonymous function that accept one parameter `x` that returns `x*x*x`, then assign this function to a variable named `y`. Any `lambda` can be called using `.call` method, for example:

```
y = ->(x){x**3}
y.call 8 # 512
```

This is equal to:

```
y = lambda {|x| x**3}
```

**Length 12** (by [Devon Parsons](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21164/devon-parsons))

```
puts "#{$$}"
```

This snippet shows a couple things. As shown below, `puts` writes to `STDOUT`. Code encapsulated in `#{ code_here }` is evaluated when the string is created, provided the string is made with double quotes. And ruby stores a bunch of useful global variables in double-character shorthand: For example, `$~` is the most recent regex match, and in this snippet, `$$` is the current process ID. So this snippet writes the current process' ID to `STDOUT`.

Coincidentally, the ID is of type `Fixnum`. The string interpolation automatically calls the `to_s` method on the evaluated code, and `to_s` by convention returns a string interpretation of the object.

**Length 11**

```
x={a:1,b:2}
```

The statement above is one (of many way to create a [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html) or commonly called associative array), to access the value, you can type `x[:a]`, where `:a` is a symbol (explained in **Length 2**). To set a value you can type `x[:key_name] = 'yayy'`. The key of a Hash could be anything not just symbol. Another popular way to create a Hash is using `=>` symbol, for example:

```
x = { 'a' => 123, 456 => [7,8,9], c: 'wow' }
# x['a'] == 123
# x[456] == [7,8,9]
# x[:c] == 'wow'
```

**Length 10**

```
[*(8..11)]
```

In this snippet, that statement has the same effect as typing: `[8,9,10,11]`. The `8..11` part is called `Range` object. The `*` operator is the splat operator, in this part, the operator has the same effect as `.to_a` to array conversion `(8..11).to_a`.

**Length 9**

```
def x;end
```

This is an example on how to create a function, that example is the same as:

```
def x
end
```

To fill the function content, you may type it before the `end` keyword, for example:

```
def x
  puts 'the x function has been called'
  123
end
```

Anything that typed before `end` keyword would be returned, so in this statement `y = x`, the `y` variable would contain `123`.

**Length 8**

```
9.to_s(2)
```

This is an example on how to perform base conversion from base-10 integer to binary number, the result would be `1001`. You can change number `2` into another base, and `.to_i` can have parameters too, to parse from `string` to number, for example `'1101'.to_i(2)` that would return `13`.

**Length 7**

```
__END__
```

`__END__` is a line keyword that denotes the end of regular source code, the lines below that line wont be executed and would be gathered in `DATA` string constant.

**Length 6**

```
rescue
```

The `rescue` keyword is Ruby's keyword to catch raised exception, we could use this as one-line, for example: `x = 1/0 rescue 2`, that would set `x` into `2`, or we could use it within `begin` and `end` keyword, for example:

```
begin
  1/0
rescue ZeroDivisionError
  puts 'zero division detected
end
```

You can find more information about ZeroDivisionError [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/ZeroDivisionError.html).

**Length 5**

```
BEGIN
```

`BEGIN` is a keyword that will execute following code-block before anything else withint the script, for example `puts 'b'; BEGIN { puts 'a' }` would give an output: `a` then `b`. There are also `END` keyword that executes next code-block before program termination.

**Length 4**

```
puts
```

This function would print a newline on the console, if you add anything as parameter for example: `puts('A')` or `puts 'A'`, this would print an `A` character then a newline.

**Length 3**

```
'A'
```

Single quote is one way to create a string, there are another way such as double quote, always use single quote for better performance when no [interpolation](http://rors.org/2008/10/26/dont-escape-in-strings) needed. To get the code-point value of a single string, use `.ord` method.

**Length 2**

```
:x
```

This is an example on how to create a symbol. Symbol starts with colon followed by quoted string, underscore or alphabet. [Symbol](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm) is an object to hold immutable string, that normally used as hash's key. To convert it to string, use `.to_s` method.

**Length 1**

```
1
```

This is an example on how you make a `Fixnum` object, fixed number is an integer. everything is an object in Ruby, they could have methods such as: `1.to_f` would return `1.0` a `Float` object, or `1.to_s` would return `"1"` a `String` object.

**Factoid**

[Gems](http://rubygems.org) is Ruby's package (library and programs) manager.

Comment: Kokizzu, why did you add so many snippets? You are only up to 13 votes

Comment: overexcited.. XD

Comment: Should be rolled back now that it's past 20!

Comment: Ruby has so many awesome features! Why have I never bothered to learn to use it?

Comment: @ETHproductions I have no idea why Python was chosen over it as a learning language. Ruby is simpler at first and much more powerful after you learn the basics.

Answer (score 31):

### [SAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAS_(software))

**Factoid:**

SAS is a data manipulation 4th generation language dating all the way back to 1966. Despite its age, it is still widely used to this day, particularly in financial and pharmaceutical environments where a large legacy codebase has been built up over the past few decades.

**Length 1**

```
;
```

To the best of my knowledge, this is the only complete and valid SAS statement of length 1 - a null statement.

**Length 2**

```
x;
```

SAS was born out of an effort to get code from one platform working on another. It has many OS-agnostic commands for interacting with the host operating system. The x statement is one of these. A null x statement opens up a command prompt / terminal for user input.

**Length 3**

```
%a:
```

As well as the primary language (consisting mainly of data steps, procs and global statements), a macro language was added in SAS 5. With 3 characters, we can define a 1-letter label for use with a macro `%goto` statement.

**Length 4**

```
run;
```

Analysts typically write SAS programs in an interactive environment (the SAS Enhanced Editor window). A `run` statement is required in order to tell SAS to execute all the (non-macro) code that's been compiled since the last run statement. As there is often a lot of back-and-forth editing and re-running of various steps within programs, it is quite common to see a `run` statement at the end of every data step and proc in a program, even though most of them are probably not necessary when running the whole thing from end to end.

**Length 5**

```
quit;
```

Some SAS procs support multiple sequentially executed `run` groups and will therefore not terminate until a `quit` statement is issued. Others do not and will throw an error if they receive a `quit` statement. Still others accept only a `quit` statement and will throw an error if they receive a `run` statement. Working out which are which can be rather frustrating for new users.

**Length 6**

```
set a;
```

SAS data steps usually operate in an implicit loop from an initial `data` statement to a final `run` statement (or the start of another data step, global statement, or proc). Each time a `set` statement is executed, SAS reads the next record from the input sas dataset(s) into an area of memory known as the Program Data Vector, where individual variables can be manipulated with data step functions until the end of that iteration of the data step is reached and the record is written to the output file or dataset. This process repeats until the last record has been read from the input dataset and duly processed.

**Length 7**

```
link a;
```

SAS has two different versions of `goto` !

`link` and `goto` statements will both send you to a label elsewhere in the data step, but the difference between them is what happens when you subsequently reach a (possibly implicit) return statement. If you last came from a `goto` statement, you go back to the start of the implicit data step loop for a new iteration, but if you last came from a `link` statement, you go back to the statement just after the (most recent) `link` statement and continue the current iteration.

Although it stops short of explicitly advising programmers not to use these statements, the SAS help file diplomatically points out that

> GO TO statements can often be replaced by DO-END and IF-THEN/ELSE
>   programming logic.

**Length 8**

```
%let a=;
```

This creates/overwrites a zero-character macro variable `a`. It may be local or global, depending on whether the `%let` statement runs within a macro or in open code. It can be referred to elsewhere in the program as `&a`. Syntactically, this is not a special case - you never need to use quotes when defining macro variables this way, unless you want to produce a string that contains them! Also, all macro variable values are trimmed when assigned, so inserting whitespace between `=` and `;` has no effect.

**Length 9**

```
a="""''";
```

In a data step, this assigns the value `"''` to the variable `a`. SAS parses the outermost pair of double quotes first, then replaces each inner instance of two consecutive double quotes with a single double quote. The consecutive single quotes are unaffected. The converse happens if you replace the outer double quotes with single quotes.

Strange though it may seem, this functionality can actually be very useful, as it tends to be a lesser evil than using macro quoting functions. Woe betide you should you accidentally try this with an odd number of double quotes, though...

**Length 10**

```
%quote(%()
```

Loosely speaking, the macro processor resolves anything that looks like a macro call (i.e. with a preceding % sign) during compilation, and makes another pass during execution for anything that turns out to be a macro function or variable. Sometimes you need to mask characters that would normally be parsed as macro tokens, or which would otherwise affect compilation. This is one of the most fiddly aspects of SAS.

Depending on precisely what you want to do, SAS has about a dozen different macro quoting functions to choose from, which all behave slightly differently. `%quote` masks macro characters during macro execution. As demonstrated here, you can also use % characters within certain macro quoting functions to tell the macro processor not to expect a balancing quote or bracket.

**Length 11**

```
if first.a;
```

This is a common data step use case of by-group processing - one of the most distinctive features of SAS. When you use a `by` statement, SAS uses a system of input buffers to keep track of whether any of the `by` variables have changed value between iterations. E.g. to use the above snippet, you would need something like `by a;` first in your data step. Usually, this needs the dataset to be sorted in ascending order.

This snippet is equivalent to `if not(first.a) then delete;` which under most circumstances means *if the current value of `a` appeared in a previous row, stop this iteration of the data step and don't output the current row*.

**Length 12**

```
*";*';*);*/;
```

One of the joys of the SAS Enhanced Editor window - the setting in which one can run SAS code interactively - is that it is quite easy to accidentally submit an incomplete fragment of code for processing. When this happens, SAS will often appear to have stopped responding, usually because it thinks you've left a comment, bracket or quoted string open and is waiting patiently for you to close it. This snippet is an example of a 'magic string' that when submitted enough times may enable you to regain control of your session. Or not.

**Length 13**

```
data a/debug;
```

One largely forgotten component of SAS is the interactive data step debugger. This functions in a similar manner to the MS Office Visual Basic Editor, allowing you to execute iterations of a data step one line at a time and check the values of variables at each point. However, due to the amount of keyboard input required to operate the debugger once you've launched it, it's usually quicker just to modify your data step code so that it prints the equivalent diagnostic information directly to the SAS log.

**Length 14**

```
array a{2}(1);
```

In SAS, arrays are very transient things - merely a way to pick variables from a list numerically rather than by name for the duration of a data step. Once it finishes executing, the variables may still be present somewhere, but the array is gone.

When called in a data step, this snippet creates a numeric array called `a` containing two elements, which are auto-named `a1` and `a2`. `a1` is initialised (to 1) but `a2` is not and takes the missing value `.`.The elements can be referred to as `a[i]`, where `i` is a numeric variable or constant. Values of the array variables are retained across observations. The elements of a can be referred to as `a[i]`, where `i` is a numeric variable or constant.

The second set of brackets are required to be round brackets `()`, but the first set can be replaced with square brackets `[]` or braces `{}`. Similarly, you can use any of these when referring to array elements in code.

**Length 15**

```
a='01jan1960'd;
```

We finally have enough characters to show an example of using a SAS date literal. The SAS date epoch is 1st January 1960, so this snippet is equivalent to `a=0;`. The core SAS language has no concept of data types beyond character and numeric, so even though we've used a date literal there's no way to distinguish between the raw output of these two statements. It's important to note that literals don't behave the same way in the macro language - if you ran something like `%let a='01jan1960'd;` then the resulting macro variable would be treated as a string until it was evaluated within a core language statement or function.

**Length 16**

```
where a=*"John";
```

Compared to some other languages, SAS has a modest set of operators (perhaps unsurprisingly, given the limited number of types). However, SAS still found space to include one for [SOUNDEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) matching. When included in a data step or proc, this line restricts the input to records where the variable `a` sounds like `John` - e.g. `Jane` would match. Unlike most other SAS operators, the sounds-like operator is only valid in where clauses, not in more general expressions.

**Length 18**

```
input a is8601dt.;
```

One of the strongest features of SAS is its ability to read data stored in practically any imaginable format with a relatively modest amount of code. The `input` statement has quite a complex syntax and can be challenging to use, but offers the greatest flexibility when reading in external data out of all the available methods in SAS.

The snippet above uses the built-in `is8601dt.` datetime informat to read in text of the form `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss` from the start of each line of an input file and store it as a numeric SAS datetime variable `a`. E.g. the text `2014-12-31T23:59:59` would be stored as `1735689599` - the number of seconds since 1st January 1960.

**Length 19**

```
proc means noprint;
```

One curious historical quirk of SAS is that it has ended up with two procs that calculate summary statistics for datasets, with near-identical features and syntax - `proc means` and `proc summary`. In early versions of SAS these were distinct procs, but over the decades they've converged to the point where they now share a help page. This example highlights one of the few remaining differences - `proc means` will output to the listing area by default, unless as here you tell it not to, whereas `proc summary` doesn't. Although this is a valid SAS statement, it is not a complete call to the proc - at a bare minimum, to request default statistics for the last used dataset, you would need to add a `run;` afterwards.

**Length 20**

```
data a(index=(var));
```

Another strength of SAS is its ability to crunch through vast volumes of data on disk, without requiring similarly vast amounts of memory - this has historically been one of the main advantages of SAS over R, though in recent years R has been catching up. As with other DBMS software, indexes help tremendously when you only need to extract a small proportion of records. This statement tells SAS to index the variable `var` when creating the dataset `a`.

When working with particularly huge datasets, normal SAS indexes can prove inadequate due to their rather generalised design - as a result, people have developed [their own more specialised ones](http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2011/BB16.Keintz.pdf).

**Length 21**

```
%macro a(b,c=);%mend;
```

We now have enough characters available to define a trivial macro. In SAS a macro is simply a way of generating text, which is then interpreted as if it were non-macro code. Eventually, anyway - sometimes multiple passes are required to resolve all macro tokens.

Our macro could called like so:

```
%a(1,c=2);
```

This would create two local macro variables, with values b=1 and c=2, and then exit, generating no further code. In SAS-speak, b is a *positional parameter* of %a, and c is a *keyword parameter*. Positional parameters, when specified, must always go before keyword parameters (and in the correct order) when calling a macro, unless you refer to them by name. E.g.

```
%a(c=2, b=1); /*Assigns both values as expected*/
%a(c=2);      /*Sets &b to an empty string*/
%a(c=2, 1);   /*Throws an error*/
```

**Length 22**

```
%let a=a;%put &a.&&&a;
```

This is a highly circuitous method of printing the text `aa` to the SAS log. The initial `%put &a` is straightforward enough- this simply resolves `&a` to its value `a`. The `.` tells SAS that it has reached the end of the name of the macro variable, and is not printed. What happens with `&&&a` is more complex. In the first pass through the code, the macro processor resolves `&a` to `a`, its assigned value, and resolves `&&` to `&`. In the second pass, the macro processor sees only `&a` and resolves this to `a`, which is then appended to the `a` from earlier and printed to the log. If you need to go several layers of variables in, the number of `&` signs required increases exponentially.

**Length 23**

```
proc datasets lib=work;
```

This has been described as the 'Swiss Army Knife of SAS procs', and with good reason. As well as listing, copying, appending, deleting and renaming SAS files (including, but not limited to, datasets), it can also be used to make all sorts of changes to the metadata *within* SAS datasets - things like variable names, formats and so on - without having to run a wasteful data step that overwrites the whole dataset. It is among the minority of procs that allow multiple `run;` groups (as mentioned in example 5), and requires a final `quit;` statement after the last one. This modest example lists the contents of the temporary work library.

**Length 24**

```
dcl hash h(dataset:'a');
```

Hash objects were first made available in SAS 9.1. The above statement, when run in a data step, declares and instantiates a hash object `h` containing variables from the dataset `a`. This is cheating slightly, as some additional statements are required to declare the key variable(s) you want to use to store/retrieve items in the hash, and optionally some data variables associated with each combination of keys. The most common use of hash objects is for merging small datasets onto much larger ones, as using a hash lookup to retrieve values from a small dataset avoids having to sort the other (much larger) dataset.

**Length 25**

```
proc format cntlin=a;run;
```

Before we had hash objects, the next best thing was a *format merge*. This worked by defining a custom format to translate lookup keys to lookup values, effectively resulting in the lookup dataset being loaded into memory. This snippet takes a specially structured dataset `a` and uses it to define one or more formats.

Format merges can outperform hash merges if you only need to look up one variable from your lookup dataset, but they have some limitations. A format can only be applied to one variable, so if your lookup depends on a combination of keys, you have to concatenate them - a messy process. Each key can then only be mapped to one value per format, so if you have multiple lookup variables you end up having to load the keys from the lookup dataset into memory multiple times - distinctly sub-optimal for larger lookup datasets.

Comment: I've been a SAS programmer by title for quite a while now and this is the first time I've seen `link`. Interesting.

Comment: In my defence, I've never actually used it.

Comment: Nice.  Hopefully we get a few more votes so the more fun bits of SAS can be explained.  I was pleasantly surprised to find this on the first page :)  One fun factoid from me: someone wrote a fully functional (ie, playable) Wolfenstein 3D emulator in SAS a decade or so ago.

Comment: @Joe: That's incredible! Do you have a link to it or related information?

Comment: @user3490: It's useful to note that SAS has no concept of data types beyond character and numeric, _except in the DS2 and FedSQL procedures_, which feature multiple data types.

Comment: @Alex http://wolfensas.subshock.net/ .  I'm not sure how well it behaves on newer machines/etc., but it used to work at least...  it uses SAS to talk to DirectX, I believe.

Comment: @Joe: This is absurd. Unfortunately I'm not admin on my work computer (the one that has SAS installed) and I don't think I can justify asking IT to install the font file that's required to play the game...

Comment: @Alex - I'd still say that the core SAS language has no other types. By the way - I've tested wolfensas and can confirm that it still works on 9.x.

Comment: The fact that Wolfensas even exists makes me so happy.

Comment: @Joe, I do not think Wolfensas does interacts with DirectX.  All graphics seem to just use the SAS window statement and custom fonts.  It does interact with several other windows components, but from my quick glance, mostly for the network/multiplayer functionality and I believe tracking the cursor/mouse clicks.  I remember finding this years ago and it also made me very happy.

Comment: I'm very happy to see the "magic string" included.

Answer (score 31):

### IBM Enterprise COBOL

**Factoid:** Whilst it is possible (twists and turns) to have a useful two-character program (to be the target of a CALL to a sub-program which doesn't otherwise exist yet), other than variations of the same thing, the next one would come in at 26 characters, and would be a variation which... doesn't work.

Plus that is not counting the mandatory seven blanks at the start of a line. And it would be severely abusing the language.

COBOL's not really so good for this challenge.

This is becoming interesting in itself. Although it will be a while before I can get the program to do something else, it is an interesting academic voyage of discovery.

Remembering that these are short, and abused, programs it is interesting that only valid COBOL can be ignored, if invalid it gets an S-level diagnostic, which is going too far. Some actually valid COBOL will not work without a full-stop/period, as I've noticed when trying to Golf(!) things previously.

**Two characters**

Excellent. Here's the two-character example. Remembering, sorry about that, that it must be preceded by seven blanks.

```
   ID
```

Doesn't look like much of a program. Certainly not much of a COBOL program. You do have to bend things a little.

Compile it, and these are the diagnostic messages you get:

```
 1  IGYDS1102-E   Expected "DIVISION", but found "END OF PROGRAM".
 "DIVISION" was assumed before "END OF PROGRAM". 

 1  IGYDS1082-E   A period was required.  A period was assumed 
 before "END OF PROGRAM". 

                  Same message on line:      1 

 1  IGYDS1003-E   A "PROGRAM-ID" paragraph was not found. 
 Program-name "CBLNAM01" was assumed.
```

That gets you a Return Code/Condition Code of eight. Normally you wouldn't generate the code for, or attempt to execute, a program with an RC/CC higher than four. However, none of those messages affect the generated code (except the allocation of a Program-name).

What does the program do? When it is CALLed, it simply returns to where it was called from, in the normal manner.

How would you use it?

Whilst developing a program, you want to check out the control flow, but you haven't written a couple of the sub-programs yet. Simply copy the loadmodule (created by feeding the object code produced into the linkeditor/binder) to the name of the CALLed program and, assuming you are using Dynamic CALLs, you have a stub which is just going to give you back control. For a Dynamically-called program, the PROGRAM-ID (Program-name) is irrelevant, so it does not matter if you accept the generated name.

An equivalent "real" program would be this.

```
   ID DIVISION. 
   PROGRAM-ID. Anything.
```

**Alternate two-character** (didn't know about this before)

```
   FD
```

Diagnostics

```
    IGYDS1000-E   A "IDENTIFICATION DIVISION" header was not found 
    in this program.  It was assumed present. 

    IGYDS1003-E   A "PROGRAM-ID" paragraph was not found. 
    Program-name "CBLNAM01" was assumed. 

 1  IGYDS1022-E   A data-name or file-name definition was found 
                  outside of the "DATA DIVISION".  Scanning was 
                  resumed at the next area "A" item or the start of
                  the next entry. 

 1  IGYSC1082-E   A period was required.  A period was assumed 
 before "END OF PROGRAM".
```

Note the lack of line-number for the first two messages. This time, with an ID, there is no line-number to associate those messages with.

**Three characters** also didn't know

```
    1 A
```

Diagnostics

```
    IGYDS1000-E   A "IDENTIFICATION DIVISION" header was not found 
    in this program.  It was assumed present. 

    IGYDS1003-E   A "PROGRAM-ID" paragraph was not found. 
    Program-name "CBLNAM01" was assumed. 

 1  IGYDS1022-E   A data-name or file-name definition was found 
                  outside of the "DATA DIVISION".  Scanning was 
                  resumed at the next area "A" item or the start of
                  the next entry. 

 1  IGYSC1082-E   A period was required.  A period was assumed 
 before "END OF PROGRAM".
```

This program defines a group-item (valid for this purpose) but it is discarded.

Program operates as above.

**Four characters**

Since it is COBOL, we should see a full-stop/period at some time. Now.

```
   1 A.
```

Even though the line is discarded, it gets one less diagnostic because the program source now ends with a full-stop/period.

**Five characters**

We're up to five votes, so here's a five character program that is equivalent:

```
   ID FD
```

This operates in exactly the same way as the two-character example. FD is valid COBOL, so the compiler realises there is some stuff missing. Without it being valid COBOL, there would be an S-level message, and an RC/CC of 12. With it being a valid COBOL word, but obviously out of place, the third messages shows that it is just ignored.

```
 1  IGYDS1102-E   Expected "DIVISION", but found "FD".  "DIVISION" 
 was assumed before "FD". 

 1  IGYDS1082-E   A period was required.  A period was assumed 
 before "FD". 

 1  IGYDS1022-E   A data-name or file-name definition was found 
                  outside of the "DATA DIVISION".  Scanning was 
                  resumed at the next area "A" item or the start of
                  the next entry. 

 1  IGYDS1003-E   A "PROGRAM-ID" paragraph was not found. 
 Program-name "CBLNAM01" was assumed. 

 1  IGYSC1082-E   A period was required.  A period was assumed 
 before "END OF PROGRAM".
```

**Six characters**

```
   ID 1 A
```

Combining a two character and a three characters, which need to be separated.

Diagnostics similar to the five-character solution.

**Seven characters**

```
   LINKAGE
```

That's a reserved-word used (followed by the word SECTION) to identify the data-items which are defined elsewhere and whose addresses are made available by a CALL from another program. Its inclusion doesn't affect our existing program :-)

Diagnostics

```
    IGYDS1003-E   A "PROGRAM-ID" paragraph was not found. 
    Program-name "CBLNAM01" was assumed. 

 1  IGYDS1000-E   A "IDENTIFICATION DIVISION" header was not found
 in this program.  It was assumed present. 

 1  IGYDS1005-E   The "DATA DIVISION" header was not found.  A 
 "DATA DIVISION" header was assumed before "LINKAGE". 

 1  IGYDS1103-E   Expected "SECTION", but found "END OF PROGRAM". 
 "SECTION" was assumed before "END OF PROGRAM". 

 1  IGYDS1082-E   A period was required.  A period was assumed 
 before "END OF PROGRAM". 

                  Same message on line:      1
```

A little more interesting this time. That "Same message on line:      1" looks odd (as the other message it is the same as is also line 1) but that is because we only have a one-line program and there are two required full-stops/periods (should be one after the SECTION which isn't there and one to end the source program).

Comment: Needs more votes to show the true characteristics of COBOL.

Comment: "the next one would come in at 26 characters" and we have 30 votes.  What now?

Answer (score 31):

## [Rust](http://rust-lang.org/)

Rust is a general purpose, multi-paradigm, compiled programming language developed by Mozilla Research. It is designed to be a "safe, concurrent, and fast."

[Link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/45032/edit) for myself, or anyone who wants to contribute to this answer.

These snippets are subject to change, since Rust syntax are not yet [stable](http://blog.rust-lang.org/2014/10/30/Stability.html). Please give a comment when there are things that no longer work on latest [Rust](http://www.rust-lang.org/install.html).

**Length 75**

```
fn a<T:Default>(v: T,p:&Display) -> T { println!("{:?}",p); T::default() }
```

For any Type that implements `T` (the default trait) and that calls function `a` in your code, the compiler will create a dedicated function that only that type will call and use. This is called monomorphization.

At the same time, all these new functions accept a value `p`, as a fat pointer (A pointer to the value, and the display implementation of that value).

These new functions can display the value `p` by *dynamic dispatch* (invoked by println!).

**Length 9**

```
fn main()
```

The `main()` function is the main function. Here's the example of hello world

```
fn main() { println!("hello world"); }
```

If saved as `hello.rs`, the source can be compiled and run using this command:

```
rustc hello.rs && ./hello
```

**Length 8**

```
fn x(){}
```

This is an example on how to create a function named `x`. The arguments can be written inside `()`, the statements or expressions can be written inside `{}`, and the return type can be written between `){` sign, for example:

```
fn x(a:i32, b:i32) -> i32 {
  if a == 0 { return b; }
  a + b // equal to return a+b;
}
```

The `return` keyword used to exit the function. Just like Ruby, the last expression in the end of the program will be returned when `return` statement not visited at runtime. Here's the exact same function without `return` keyword:

```
fn x(a:i32, b:i32) -> i32 {
  if a == 0 { b } else { a + b }
}
```

**Length 7**

```
if x {}
```

This is the `if` syntax of rust, this part similar to `Go`'s `if` syntax. We could also write like this:

```
let y = if z == 3 { 9 } else if z > 3 { 12 } else { 15 };
```

**Length 6**

```
print!
```

The `print!` and `println!` is the standard output function. This function has similar syntax to `.NET`'s [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. Here's some example:

```
print!("{0} {1} {0}",123,234);     // 123 234 123
println!("{} {} {}",123,234,345);  // 123 234 345
print!("{a} {b} {c}",a=1,c=2,b=3); // 1 3 2
```

The `{}` symbol are called `next argument` specifier, `{number}` is positional parameter, and `{string}` is named parameter, we could mix any of them. To print the type of a value, you can use `:?` debug traits, see this [link](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#formatting-traits) for another formatting traits.

```
println!("{:?}", 123 );
// 123i32

println!("{:?}", "abc" );
// "abc"

println!("{:?}", std::io::stdin().read_line() );
// some possible outcomes:
//  Ok("string that has been read\n")
//  Err(IoError { kind: EndOfFile, desc: "end of file", detail: None })

println!("{:?}", std::io::stdin().read_line().ok() );
// some possible outcomes:
//  Some("string that has been read\n")
//  None

println!("{:?}", std::io::stdin().read_line().ok().expect("Fatal: read_line failed!") );
// some possible outcomes:
//  "string that has been read\n"
//  thread '<main>' panicked at 'Fatal: read_line failed!', /build/rust/src/rustc-1.0.0-alpha/src/libcore/option.rs:330 
//  ^ this one not entering the println! function
```

**Length 5**

```
stdin
```

The `stdin` is a function that could access the standard input (when called, it returns a `std::io::stdio::StdinReader` type), usage example:

```
let s = std::io::stdin().read_line().ok().expect("Fatal: read_line failed!");
```

Or we may type:

```
use std::io::stdin; // outside function
let s = stdin().read_line().ok()
               .expect("Fatal: read_line failed!");
```

The `.ok()` part would check if `read_line` failed and the `.expect("Fatal: read_line failed!")` part would exit the program when it does.

**Length 4**

```
true
```

Just like common programming languages, this is a constant with type `bool`. As you can guess, the other value named `false`. There are another primitive type in Rust, for example `char` (32-bit unicode), that can be initialized using single quote. To convert char to string, use `.to_string()` method.

**Length 3**

```
let
```

The `let` keyword is the keyword to declare a variable, here's some example on how to use it:

```
let x = 1;
let (y, z) = (3, 4);
let a : u64 = 18446744073709551610;
```

The variable defined by `let` keyword are immutable, to make it mutable, add `mut` keyword, for example:

```
let mut b = 123;
b = 234;
```

**Length 2**

```
""
```

This is an example on how to create an empty string slices (slice of `u8`) or `&str`. This string saved on the program's binary, and cannot be mutated/deleted within runtime. There are another type of string in Rust, a mutable one, that called `String`. To convert between `&str` and `String` use `.to_string()` method, that copies the old string into another place so it can be modified (mutated). To convert `String` to `&str`, use `.as_slice()` method.

**Length 1**

```
1
```

This an example of valid number literal, to force it as `unsigned` add a suffix `u` or `_u` (uint), some other suffix exists such as `i` (int), `u8`, `i8`, `u16`, `i16`, `u32`, `i32`, `u64`, `i64`, `f`, `f32`, and `f64`.

**Factoid**

Rust has certain design [philosophy](http://doc.rust-lang.org/complement-design-faq.html):

- Memory safety must never be compromised
- Abstraction should be zero-cost, while still maintaining safety
- Practicality is key

Comment: Tell me more... in, er, 2 characters..?

Comment: that's hard.. XD lemme study first in 5 minutes..

Comment: I don't know if this could persist for a long time http://codebunk.com/b/55619431/ for backup: http://pastie.org/9865143

Comment: This is the first time I've heard about Rust. +1 for luring me in. Looking forward to seeing more.

Comment: @Kokizzu CodeBunk persists for a long long time

Comment: too bad I'm no longer interested in `Rust`. `Go` ftw!

Answer (score 30):

## Perl

**Factoid:** Though people occasionally stylize Perl as "PERL," it is in fact [not an acronym](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq1.html#Whats-the-difference-between-perl-and-Perl-).

**Note:** This has been relinquished to the community as a wiki. Please feel free to [add snippets](/posts/45018/edit) as you see fit, but please try to retain the formatting used for snippets 1-6 since it looks so clean. :)

---

**Length 27**

```perl
sub{ $_=shift; lc }->('SE')
```

An anonymous subroutine: that is, one with no name. This one is followed immediately by `->(...)` for its arguments. This snippet also demonstrates a number of other features:

(1) [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) acts on an array, lopping off the initial element and returning it; (2) `@_` is the array holding all the arguments passed to a subroutine; (3) `shift` with no arguments, in a subroutine, acts on `@_`. Thus, the first statement in our subroutine assigns to the variable `$_` the first argument passed to the subroutine, in this case `'SE'`.

(4) [`lc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html) returns the lowercasified version of a string (without changing the original variable if the argument is a variable); (5) `lc` with no arguments acts on `$_`. Thus, here, `lc` acts on `$_` which is `'SE'` and returns `'se'`.

(6) If you reach the end of a subroutine (and thus haven't yet returned anything), the subroutine returns the return value of its last statement, if any. Thus, in this case, the subroutine returns `'se'`.

Note: Many of these features are very useful in code golf; in real life, for clarity's sake, you will often want to specify the arguments to functions rather than relying on default arguments like `$_`, and to specify return values of subroutines rather than relying on the return value of the last statement (especially if the last statement is complex).

---

**Length 26**

```perl
join '', split /\W/, $foo;
```

This demonstrates using a function (with its arguments, or a unary operator) as an argument to another function or unary operator. When, as here, the first function is the **final** parameter of the other, you usually don't need parentheses to disambiguate. They may be useful for clarity in some cases, but the `join... split...` construct is so well-known that you don't need parentheses here.

[`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) takes two arguments. (Well, it can take zero to three, but it takes two in this case.) It splits the string `$foo` along demarcations matching the regular expression `/\W/`, and its return value is a list of the remaining substrings. [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) puts those back together with the empty string between them. (Incidentally, `$foo =~ s/\W//g` is a simpler way to accomplish the same thing.)

---

**Length 25**

```perl
sub foo {
    return 1;
}
```

Our first subroutine! In a later snippet, we'll see how to use arguments (parameters) passed to a subroutine; for now, our subroutine just returns `1` back to whatever called it. Our subroutine is called `foo`; anonymous subroutines are also possible and will be covered in a later snippet.

---

**Length 24**

```perl
my $has_nums = $x=~/\d+/
```

See the length-23 snippet. Like that one, this, too, binds `$x` to a regular expression, and almost the same one. (Like `/(\d+)/`, it looks for a string of digits.) But this one is being assigned to `$has_nums` rather than to a list, so it's being called in scalar context. The binding operator `=~` in scalar context, when the right-hand side is `/.../`, returns `1` (which is true) or the empty string (which is false) depending on whether the match succeeds. So now you can use `$has_nums` in `if $has_nums`, for example. (What `=~` returns in scalar context is different if its right-hand side is `s/.../.../` or some other things.)

---

**Length 23**

```perl
my ($num) = $x=~/(\d+)/
```

This demonstrates `=~`, called the binding operator. It binds (in this case) `$x` to the regular expression `/(\d+)/`. Like just about everything in Perl, this operator returns something, and what it returns depends on what context it's called in. Assigning the binding operator's return to a list `($num)` is calling it in list context. The binding operator in list context, when it's binding to just a regular expression `/.../`, returns the list of matches to the stuff in parentheses in the regular expression, which in this case is `\d+`, a string of digits. So `$num` is assigned to the first string of digits within `$x`. (What `=~` returns in list context is different if its right-hand side is `/.../g` or `s/.../.../` or other things.) See also the length-24 snippet.

---

**Length 22**

```perl
$x = 1==0 ? 'a' : 'b';
```

`... ? ... : ...` is the ternary operator. It has precedence over comparison operators like `==` but not over assignment operators like `=`, so the above means the same as `$x = ( (1==0) ? 'a' : 'b')`.

---

**Length 21**

```perl
if ($x) {
    # ...
}
```

This demonstrates Perl comments, which are from `#` to the end of the line, and the common practice of indenting four spaces for clarity. (There are other ways to comment, too, but those will have to wait for a later snippet. This snippet also tests `$x` for truthiness, but truthiness, too, will have to wait.)

---

**Length 20**

```perl
next LBL if $x >= 0;
```

This demonstrates Perl's use of postfix `if`. (It means the same as `if ($x >= 0) {next LBL;}`.) Postfix control-flow statements are usually (outside of golfing) reserved for things like `next` and `last` and `warn` and `die` where the point of postfixing is to draw attention to the crucial command being conditionally executed.

---

**Length 19**

```perl
$_ = 'quux';
print;
```

This demonstrates Perl's use of a default input for (many) built-in functions. If you don't say *what* you want to `print` (or `lcfirst` or `sqrt` or `split` or…), Perl will do it to `$_`. (The same is true for binding to a pattern match, and `$_` is the default scalar used in other circumstances also — but those will have to wait for a later snippet.) For clarity and to ensure you're using the variable you think you're using, it's often best to use some variable other than `$_`.

---

**Length 18**

```perl
@hsh{'Ann', 'Bob'}
```

This is a hash [slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices). As in the Length 17 note, below, the `{...}` (rather than `[...]`) signifies that `%hsh` is a hash. And the `@` sigil here signifies we're making a list of our hash values. Which hash values? The ones with the keys listed. So if `%hsh` is `('Ann' => 123, 'Bob' => 345, 'Cam' => 567)` then `@hsh{'Ann', 'Bob'}` is `(123, 345)`.

---

**Length 17**

```perl
$ary[0] = $hsh{a}
```

`$` is the sigil for a scalar. But an element of an array, or a value of a hash, is a scalar. So even though may call an array `@ary` and a hash `%hsh`, their values are `$ary[...]` and `$hsh{...}`. The type of bracket indicates whether it's an array or a hash.

---

**Length 10**

```perl
print$x=<>
```

This is a “one-line `cat`” program: it outputs one line of its input, then exits.  It demonstrates several features of the language.  The null filehandle is used again, now to assign a line of input to the variable `$x`.  This assignment also *returns* the value, which is then printed to STDOUT.  But wait!  Didn't `<>` return the *whole file* in Snippet 7, not just one line?  Perl statements know about the “context” they're evaluated in.  In “scalar context”, `<>` reads one line.  In “list context” it reads (“slurps”) the whole file at once; the result is a list with one element for each line.  `print` provides a list context (and concatenates its argument list), but assignment to the scalar variable `$x` enforces scalar context.

---

**Length 7:**

```perl
print<>
```

This, like `cat`, prints back its input.  The `<>` is the “null filehandle”; its lack of a name means that it reads from the “magical” filehandle `ARGV`, which sequentially opens and reads from filenames given as line arguments, or `STDIN` if there are no arguments (just like `cat` does).  In the full form, the filehandle goes between the angle brackets: `<FILEHANDLE>` may also be spelled `readline(*FILEHANDLE)`.

---

**Length 6:**

```perl
Int $x
```

Perl 5 is all dynamic typing. But Perl 6 supports both static and dynamic typing! It's one of the many ways in which the two versions have diverged.

---

**Length 5:**

```perl
'$x'
```

This may seem trivial but it's something that can confuse people new to Perl who are familiar with other languages. In some languages, it doesn't matter whether you use single or double quotes. It does in Perl, though. If you have a variable `$x` equal to 5, `"$x"` returns `"5"` and `'$x'` returns `'$x'`. Perl interprets things in double quotes but uses anything in single quotes literally.

---

**Length 4:**

```perl
less
```

The Perl pragma to [use less of something](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/perl/lib/less.pm), available in CPAN. Examples include `use less 'fat';` for those on a diet, or `use less 'CPU';` for those whose computers are on diets. The class method `less->of('x')` will tell you if `use less 'x';` was specified. Unless you take advantage of that class method in some way, specifying `use less` is useless. (See what I did there?)

---

**Length 3:**

```perl
use
```

Perl is extensible via modules, which are loaded using `use`. Other things use `use` too. Show self-discipline; `use strict; use warnings;` in your programs.

---

**Length 2:**

```perl
$!
```

Oh no, something has gone wrong! The program has died, be it intentionally (via `die`) or by the will of Zeus. But why oh *why* has execution stopped? At last, `$!` rides the Perl camel to the rescue. It contains the error code. (There's also `$@`, which contains the error message.)

---

**Length 1:**

```perl
;
```

Like so many other 1 character answers here, `;` is a valid Perl statement which does nothing. On its own it's about as useful as vacuuming a block of tofu.

Comment: It seems snippet 10 isn't really a `cat`.  With perl 5.18, at least, it prints only one line.  To echo all the input, one could write e.g. `print(<>);` (which is ten characters long) or `print $x=<> until eof` (which is slightly smarter).

Comment: @xebtl: I think it was PhiNotPi who did snippet 10. I made this a community wiki so go ahead and make changes as you see fit. :)

Comment: How about this?  If it is too repetitive, we can delete Snippet 7 again.  Perl is so full of features worth showcasing!

Comment: @xebtl: Looks good to me. Note that some features not covered here may already be covered by ASCIIThenANSI's Perl submission.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI: If you have more to share that you didn't cover in your Perl answer, you're welcome to contribute to this community wiki.

Comment: Fun Fact: Snippet 5 also applies to PHP ;)

Answer (score 29):

## F#

F# is a strongly typed, multi-paradigm programming language that encompasses functional, imperative, and object-oriented programming techniques.

All the snippets included here can be run online at: http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn
(exception: FSI snippet).

**Length 9 Snippet**

```
(10, "Z")
```

Tuples! a **Tuple** is defined as a comma separated collection of values. While **Lists** (and **Arrays**) gravitate towards the concept of a *Set*, Tuples are more like a data *structure* that groups related values.

The snippet defines a 2-tuple. One value is integer, the other string. F# annotates the type as: `int * string`

Tuples are considered ad hoc types, so they are passed as a single argument, can be a return type and so on.

F# has two built in functions to help with tuples: `fst` and `snd` that return the first or second element of a Tuple respectively. Tuples are not limited to just two elements, though.

**Length 8 Snippet**

```
[-9..10]
```

F# allows to define ranges of sequential values. This snippet generates a list of 20 integer elements, -9 and 10 inclusive.

You can define stepping values, for example `[0..10..50]` will yield a list of 6 elements: **[0; 10; 20; 30; 40; 50]**.

The range syntax is the same for lists and arrays.

**Length 7 Snippet**

```
let a=1
```

We can now define **values**. Values in F# are immutable by default, that is the reason we avoid the use of the term "variable".

The snippet defines an immutable value "a" that contains a 1 (integer).

**Length 6 Snippet**

```
2.**8.
```

Now we can use the Power function.

Note that I could not call the Power function before with arguments "2" and "8", because [the arguments] would be considered integers. The decimal points make the compiler to infer a floating point number. This snippet correctly returns a 256.0 (float) value.

Floats in F# are double precision.

**Length 5 Snippet**

```
[|0|]
```

At five characters, we can define an array with one element (as mentioned before, the compiler infers the type to `int[]`).

Not to be confused with a list. An empty list is defined simply by the square brackets like this: `[]`

The element separator, in both lists and arrays, is the semicolon (`;`) as in `[| 1;2;3 |]`

**Length 4 Snippet**

```
(**)
```

It's not an emoticon, it is a multi-line comment in F#. For some odd reason I didn't find this syntax intuitive. I got used to it until much later.

Single-line comments are double-slash (`//`), just like C++, C#, Java, etc.

**Length 3 Snippet**

```
nan
```

Three characters unlocks many basic arithmetic operations (**1+2**, **9*9** and so on). But I picked `nan`. It is a shortcut function that simply returns System.Double.NaN.

Useful to compare (or match) the result of a function.

**Length 2 Snippet**

```
;;
```

I could've used an empty string (`""`) as the snippet. That would create a function that returns an empty string, but it is the same concept as the length 1 snippet.

Instead, I picked the empty statement in **F# Interactive (FSI)**. FSI is a REPL tool that allows you to declare, construct and otherwise experiment with your code in an interactive manner and it is very useful. In my opinion, the `;;` is used more frequently than empty strings.

You must append double semicolons (`;;`) at the end of your statements in FSI to indicate the end of input.

**Length 1 Snippet**

```
0
```

A function that returns zero (the compiler infers the type to integer). Commonly used as the final statement to return the program exit code.

**Factoid**: F# uses type inference. The programmer does not need to declare types - the compiler deduces types during compilation.

Comment: Just FYI: Mathematica has the same syntax for multiline comments so it's not all that foreign. :)

Answer (score 29):

## [PHP](http://php.net)

PHP is a server-side scripting language designed for web development but also used as a general-purpose programming language. As of January 2013, PHP was installed on more than 240 million websites (39% of those sampled) and 2.1 million web servers. Originally created by Rasmus Lerdorf in 1994, the reference implementation of PHP (powered by the Zend Engine) is now produced by The PHP Group. While PHP originally stood for Personal Home Page, it now stands for PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor, which is a recursive backronym.

[Link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/44806/edit) for myself, or anyone who wants to contribute to this answer.

**Length 16**

The function

```
http_build_query
```

builds a query string for an URI from an associative array.
One of many functions that´s closely connected to web development.

**Length 15**

```
array_intersect
```

This function returns the common elements of two or more arrays.

Array function names in PHP are bulky. Apart from `implode` and `explode` (respectively `join` and `split`), they are almost always prefixed.

**Length 14**

```
imagefilledarc
```

Since version 4.0.6, php has builtin image processing with some pretty sophisticated functions. `imagefilledarc` is one of them. It can be used e.g. for painting a three dimensional pie chart.

**Length 13**

```
if($a >= $b):
```

This is the alternative syntax for control structures, which ends when it finds a `endif;` statement. This syntax can be used with if, while, for, foreach, and switch, and end with `endif;` `endwhile;` `endfor;` `endforeach;` or `endswitch;` respectively. This alternative syntax is most used to output html without echoing html tags:

```
<?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
<p><?php echo $item; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Length 12**

```
function(){}
```

This is an example of anonymous function, that can be assigned to a variable, or passed as parameter, for example:

```
$cmp = function($a,$b) {
  if($a<$b) return -1;
  if($a>$b) return 1;
  return 0;
};
$arr = array(3,1,2);
usort($arr,$cmp);
print_r($arr); // array( [0] => 1, [1] => 2, [2] => 3 )
```

**Length 11**

```
['a'=>[12]]
```

This statement is equal to `array('a'=>array(12))`, this short array syntax available since PHP 5.4.

**Length 10**

```
$a=array()
```

This is an example on how to create an array, don't forget to add `;` at the end of the statement. The array will have empty length, you can check it using `sizeof` function. To append at the end of that array, you might use `[]=` operator, for example: `$a[] = 12`, this would append a number `12` to that array, that similar as typing `array(12)` at initialization.

**Length 9**

```
phpinfo()
```

This [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) will print all information about current configuration and variables on your system.

**Length 8**

```
__FILE__
```

Magic constant `__FILE__` is a constant that have different value depends on the file its being declared, there are also `__LINE__` that shows the line number where its being declared, and `__FUNCTION__` for function, `__DIR__` for directories (since PHP 5.3). You could see the full list [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php). They could be used as better way to implement includes, for example: `include dirname(__FILE__).'/file.php';` or `include __DIR__.'/file.php';`, credits: [@ismael-miguel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/14732/ismael-miguel)

**Length 7**

```
4**3**2
```

Exponentiation operator `**` is supported since PHP 5.6, the result of that execution is `262144` (from `4**9`)

**Length 6**

```
$_POST
```

This is a global variable that holds value from HTTP protocol with method `POST`, for example, if you have this form: `<form method='post'><input type='submit' name='a' value='b' /></form>'`, when that button clicked, the current PHP script could access the submitted value using `$_POST['a']` that would equal to `'b'` string.

**Length 5**

```
<?=5?>
```

This is an example to write number 5 to output, this statement equal to `<?php echo 5; ?>`, don't forget to enable `short_open_tag` in your `php.ini` to enable this feature.

**Length 4**

```
NULL
```

`NULL` is a constant that holds the value of any variable that hasn't been set yet, or have been `unset`, or any variable/constant that has been assigned as `NULL`.

**Length 3**

```
1.2
```

This is example on how to create a [float](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) type value. Do not compare float values with equality `==` operator since they are [imprecise](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/). To check whether a variable is a float type, use `is_float` function.

**Length 2**

```
''
```

This is how you create an empty string in PHP, there are other way such as double quote `""`. For performance reason, always use single quote unless there are [interpolation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

**Length 1**

```
a
```

Anything that written outside `<?` or `<?php` and `?>` are treated as output, so, if a `.php` file containing only a character `a`, that character itself would be the output.

**Factoid**

Some of the biggest [online sites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_languages_used_in_most_popular_websites), such as [Facebook](http://facebook.com), [Wikipedia](http://wikipedia.org), and [Yahoo!](http://yahoo.com) are powered by PHP.

Comment: 7 byte snippet: `array()` or `$s?1:0;`.

Comment: 8 byte snippet: `<?=text;` (it shows that you don't need the closing tag (useful for included files that aren't meant to produce output) and it shows that undefined constants are converted to strings (but raise a warning when doing so)).

Comment: When you get a lot more of upvotes, you can use this one: `<script language="php">` which is a valid opening tag. (Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)

Comment: the last one is new for me :3 thanks!

Comment: I got surprised when I found it, almost 1 year and a half ago. And you should specify that the constant `__DIR__` is only available in PHP 5.3 and up. Also, a better way to implement includes is to use `include dirname(__FILE__).'/file.php';` or `include __DIR__.'/file.php';` which increase the performance by reducing a few filesystem lookups for relative paths.

Comment: Also, a 0 byte snippet is an empty file being accessed with `?=PHPE9568F34-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42` at the end (e.g.: http://localhost/index.php?=PHPE9568F34-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42). It should display PHP's logo.

Comment: I believe the comment on `4**3**2` is incorrect. It says the result `262144` comes from `64**2`, which it does not. It comes from `4**9`, as the `**`-operator is right associative.

Comment: you're right.. *edited*

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel if I understand right, when you need a special way to call a piece of code, that is included in the count for code-golf. So that would be a 39-byte snippet.

Comment: another one for 12 or 13 bytes: `phpcredits();` creates a HTML page with info on PHP developers, authors of modules, etc.

Answer (score 29):

## LOLCODE

> Note: I will be following previous rules of this showcase before mods stepped in, in that the length of my longest snippet will be equal to the number of votes this post has.

---

#### 25 characters

```
HAI 1.3
VISIBLE 1
KTHXBYE
```

This is a complete program that prints 1 to the standard output.

#### 24 characters

```
HOW IS I z
3
IF U SAY SO
```

Defines a function `z` that when called, returns 3.

#### 23 characters

```
VISIBLE SUM OF a AN 32
```

Prints variable `a` plus 32.

#### 22 characters

```
I HAS A var
GIMMEH var
```

Create a variable and assign input to it.

#### 21 characters

```
VISIBLE “HAI WURLDZ!”
```

**The LOLCODE Hello World Program!!!** w00t w00t!

#### 20 characters

```
I HAS A big ITZ FAIL
```

Creates a variable `big` and assigns it to `FAIL`, the falsy boolean.

#### 19 characters

```
QUOSHUNT OF 99 AN 9
```

Returns `11`, 99 divided by 9.

#### 18 characters

```
I HAS A var ITZ 99
```

Creates variable `var` and assigns it the value `99`, a `NUMBR`.

#### 17 characters

```
O RLY?
YA RLY
OIC
```

Similar to the last snippet, this is a blank if statement. `O RLY?` takes the value in `IT` and tests it for truthiness. If true, it runs the code in the `YA RLY` block, then exits at `OIC`.

#### 16 characters

```
WTF?
OMGWTF
OIC
```

A switch/case statement. Takes the variable in `IT` (the runtime temporary variable) and matches it up with any `OMG <value>` statements. Since there are none, it goes right to `OMGWTF`, the default statement. Since there is no code in the block, it goes right to `OIC` and continues with the code.

#### 15 characters

```
HAI 1.3
KTHXBYE
```

The shortest complete program. All LOLCODE programs start with a version number and end with KTHXBYE.

#### 14 characters

```
DIFF OF 9 AN 6
```

Returns the difference of 9 and 6

#### 13 characters

```
CAN HAS TIME?
```

Imports the library TIME if it exists.

#### 12 characters

```
GIMMEH INPTZ
```

Gets input from STDIN and saves it to the already-defined variable INPTZ.

#### 11 characters

```
OBTW
C
TLDR
```

A multi-line comment (C is the content)

#### 10 charaters

```
VISIBLE 10
```

Prints 10 to STDOUT.

#### 9 characters

```
I HAS A Z
```

Creates a variable called Z.

#### 8 characters

```
VISIBLE
```

(note the trailing space) Prints… nothing.

#### 7 characters

```
HAI 1.3
```

The `hello()` of LOLCODE.

#### 6 characters

```
GIMMEH
```

A function asking for input from STDIN. This does nothing as it's not assigned to a variable though.

#### 5 characters

```
Y R 6
```

Assigns the `NUMBR` 6 to the already-defined variable Y

#### 4 characters

```
":)"
```

A newline inside a `YARN`. THE `:` character is the escape character inside strings.

#### 3 characters

```
BTW
```

An empty comment. w00t.

#### 2 characters

```
""
```

An empty `YARN`

#### 1 character

> <s>I cantz do real stuff with my 1 char!!</s>

<s>-- Hohmannfan</s>

```
3
```

It da `NUMBR` 3.

#### Factoid

Is composed almost completely with Internet slang.

Comment: 1 character: "I cantz do real stuff with my 1 char!!"

Comment: yah me cantz ur rite

Comment: CAN I HAZ LENGTH 10? sorry for shouting :3

Comment: YA U CAN HAZ LENF 10

Comment: `I HAZ A VAR; VAR R 12; CAN HAZ LENF R?!!??!?!; GIMMEH!`

Comment: Output: `TROOF`

Answer (score 28):

## JavaScript, EcmaScript 6

I will be focusing on features/snippets of/from ES6 standard in this answer. Some snippets require knowledge of topics previously presented, so you may want to read this bottom-to-top.

**Length 17 snippet**:

```js
"".codePointAt()
```

More Unicode support! `.codePointAt()` is a Unicode-compliant version of `.charCodeAt()`. For example, if you were to take

```js
"".charCodeAt()
```

you would find `55362`. This might seem right, but if you convert it to hexadecimal, you would find that it corresponds to U+D842. Looking on [Graphemica](http://graphemica.com), we can see that the character is actually [U+20BB7](http://graphemica.com/%F0%A0%AE%B7). U+D842 is one of the two [surrogates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF) that makes up the UTF-16 representation of that character.

But enough of these details: the point of `.codePointAt()` is to find the actual Unicode point of the character. `"".codePointAt()` is `134071`, or U+20BB7—the correct result. Finally Unicode lovers can use JavaScript!

**Length 16 snippet**:

```js
/^.$/u.test("")
```

Another nice feature of ES6 is proper Unicode support! If you tried this code in ES5:

```js
alert(/^.$/.test(""))
```

You might be surprised to find that the answer is `false`! The problem here is in JavaScript's default encoding, UTF-16: characters above U+FFFF are actually represented as 2 chars, called "surrogates". (You can learn more about this on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF).) In order to fix this, you need a more complex regex:

```js
alert(/^(?:[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|.)$/.test(""))
```

ES6 introduces the `u` flag on regexes. When `u` is set, characters above U+FFFF are still captured as a single char. So `/^.$/u.test("")` returns the correct result: `true`.

**Length 15 snippet**:

```js
String.raw`q\n`
```

Back to tagged templates! ES6 comes with a function all set up to be used as a tag: `String.raw`. This returns the raw text you typed in the template (replacing interpolations with their values), so the above snippet is equalivalent to `"q\\n"`.

**Length 14 snippet**:

```js
Number.EPSILON
```

As you may know, JavaScript's numbers are not arbitrary-precision; they have exactly 53 bits of precision. This can cause problems when trying to add decimal numbers:

```js
var point3 = 0.1 + 0.2;
alert(point3 === 0.3); // false!
```

The problem here is that neither `0.1` nor `0.2` can be represented exactly in binary, and when adding them together, the least significant bit is rounded the wrong way, resulting in `0.30000000000000004` instead of `0.3`.

`Number.EPSILON` was added as a workaround to this problem; it is equal to 2<sup>-53</sup>, the smallest number that can be added to 1 without rounding back down to 1. We can use this to create a new equals function:

```js
equals = (num1, num2) => Math.abs(num1 - num2) < Number.EPSILON;

alert(equals(point3, 0.3)); // true!
```

Hooray for ES6!

**Length 13 snippet**:

```js
s=>s.split` `
```

What is this? A function call without parentheses? Actually, it's another use of template literals: [tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals)! But what is actually happening here?

When you tag a template with a function, it calls the function as usual, but it passes in the arguments a little differently. Take this example function:

```js
function parseMe(strings, name, age) {
  alert(`Your name is ${ name } and you are ${ age } years old`);
  console.log("We don't need these strings:", strings);
}

myName = "Bob";
myAge = 123;
parseMe `Hello, I'm ${ myName } and I've orbited the earth ${ myAge } times.`;
```

This alerts `Your name is Bob and you are 123 years old`. Why? When calling a function with a tagged template, JavaScript passes each `${ }` value as a separate parameter, groups the strings into an array which is passed before everything else. So you're really calling `parseMe` like this:

```js
parseMe( ["Hello, I'm ", " and I've orbited the earth ", "times."], myName, myAge );
```

Cool, right? Now back to the original snippet. Now we can see that it could be written like this:

```js
s=>s.split([" "])
```

`.split` coerces its argument to a string before splitting. The string representation of `[" "]` is `" "`, so the function could be written yet another way:

```js
s=>s.split(" ")
```

And this simply splits the text on spaces, which splits it into words. Isn't ES6 awesome?

**Length 12 snippet**:

```js
n=>`Hi
${n}`
```

Introducing...template literals! Yet another super-helpful ES6 feature. These act like strings for the most part, but you can include newlines without escaping them. Not only that, but you can also use interpolation! If you run the above function with input `"JavaScript"`, it will output this:

```
Hi
JavaScript
```

**Length 11 snippet**:

```js
[a,b]=[b,a]
```

Tired of using that old `var tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp;` trick to swap variables? Now you don't have to! Using destructuring, you can swap those two variables quickly and concisely with the above statement.

**Length 10 snippet**:

```js
[a,...b]=b
```

Destructuring! Yay! This is one of the cooler features of ES6. You can use it to do many things that would have taken a lot more bytes in ES5. For example, this is what the above statement corresponds to in ES5:

```js
a=b[0],b=b.slice(1)
```

Actually, `a=b.unshift()` works too, but consider when you want to grab the first three items:

```js
[x,y,z,...b]=b
x=b.unshift(),y=b.unshift(),z=b.unshift()
```

Or if you don't want to change the value of `b`:

```js
[x,y,z]=b
x=b[0],y=b[1],z=b[2]
```

As you can see, destructuring is shorter, more readable, and just all-around better.

**Length 9 snippet**:

```js
new Set()
```

Another useful data-type that JavaScript now supports is Sets! You can create a set like so:

```js
var myArray = [1, 3, 6, 3, 2, 1];
var mySet = new Set(myArray);
// Set [ 1, 3, 6, 2 ]
```

As you can see, creating a Set out of an array removes all duplicate items. You can turn it back into an array with the spread operator:

```js
myArray = [...mySet];
// [ 1, 3, 6, 2 ]
```

You can also use this trick on strings:

```js
var myString = "Hello, World!";
var mySet = new Set(myString);
myString = [...mySet].join("");
// "Helo, Wrd!"
```

Keep in mind that the Set constructor must be called with `new`, and only works on the first argument. For example, this won't work:

```js
var mySet = new Set(1, 3, 6, 3, 2, 1);
// TypeError: 1 is not iterable
```

You can learn all about Sets on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

**Length 8 snippet**:

```js
(i=0)=>i
```

You probably understand what this example is: default parameters! JavaScript ES5 is really horrible with default values. Usually you can get away with this workaround:

```js
function f(i) {
  i = i || 0;
  return i;
}
```

However, this resets `i` if it is *anything* falsy (`false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, or `undefined`). To just do `null` or `undefined`, you have to be much more verbose:

```js
function f(i) {
  if (typeof i === "undefined" || i === null)
    i = 0;
  return i;
}
```

But ES6 contains a new syntax for default values! Now you can shorten your code to this:

```js
function f(i = 0) {
  return i;
}
```

Or in ES6 arrow notation, `f=(i=0)=>i`. When given an input, this just returns the input, but when called with no input, it returns `0`. This is very helpful in uncountable scenarios, and possibly one of the best additions of ES6.

**Length 6 snippet**:

```js
Symbol
```

JavaScript now supports [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)! A symbol is created with `Symbol("foo")`, and every symbol created is different: `Symbol("foo") !== Symbol("foo")` The only way to keep a symbol is to assign it to a variable: `var sym = Symbol("foo"); sym === sym`

One of the most useful Symbols is `Symbol.iterator`. This is a [Generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) which is used whenever you iterate over an object, whether with for-in loops or the `...` operator (see below). For example, the following code defines an iterator for all Number objects:

```js
Number.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    for(var i = 0; i < this; i++)
        yield i;
}
```

Now `[...6]` returns `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`! Aren't generators fun?

**Length 5 snippet**:

```js
const
```

This for a change is exactly what you've guessed! Its a new variable declaration syntax used for creating constant variables.

```js
const a = "foo";
```

Now `a`'s value is fixed, any attempt to change it will lead to a `SyntaxError` (cos JS!). Not only that, if you skip the assignment part while declaring the variable, that will also lead to a `SyntaxError`.

```js
const a;
// Exception: SyntaxError: missing = in const declaration

const a = "foo";
a = "bar";
// Exception: SyntaxError: invalid assignment to const a
```

**Length 3 snippet**:

```js
...
```

Default arguments ? Java ? Nope! This is the new [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and it does exactly what it says.

For instance, you want to spread your array variable `A` into another array `B` in the middle alongside other things:

```js
var B = [1, 2, 5, ...A, 8, 0];
```

That simple!

You can even do this with function calls or arguments.

```js
function foo(a, b, ...c) {}
```

is a function whose first argument goes in `a`, second goes in `b` and rest all arguments (third, fourth ...) go in as an array in `c`.

Now if you want to call that function and all your arguments are in the array `A`, you can do it like

```js
foo(...A);
```

**Length 2 snippet**:

```js
=>
```

Think that I put *greater than or equal to* sign the wrong way ? Think again! Think ES6!

This is one of the best features of ES6 - [Fat arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) . Apart from reducing a lot of bytes while defining a function (`var a=_=>_+_` instead of `var a = function(_){return _+_}`), arrow functions also change the behavior of `this` so that you don't have to `bind` the function again and again.

**Length 1 snippet**:

```js
*
```

Multiplication ? Nope! Remember ES6! The `*` keywords is part of one of many syntax sugar + features of ES6 - [Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). This is added to the `function` keyword to make the function a generator function.

**Factoid**

ES6 adds a lot of useful syntax sugar and features into the language inspired by a lot of other languages.

The most useful fact about ES6 is that due to the added syntax and features, it performs much better than ES5 (current generation JS across all browsers) in terms of [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

The final spec for ES6 was finalized in June 2015, and all major browsers (except IE) have enabled most of the new features. You can check [this page](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) to see which features your browser supports, as well as all major browsers and other environments.

Comment: I can't wait till ES6 is usable in production

Comment: Nice showcase of the new features! Could you add a few more, please? :-)

Comment: Sure, I'll try to update today or tomorrow.

Comment: ^‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌ ;)

Comment: Well, this answer now has 18 upvotes, could you update it?

Comment: May I please add a few snippets?

Comment: @ETHproductions please feel free to! thanks in advance!

Comment: @Gothdo It now has 23 upvotes, and I'm in the process of updating it :)

Answer (score 28):

## [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/)

OpenSCAD is a language used to create parametric and accurate 3d models using nothing but code.
Note: I refer to CSG multiple times in this post; this stands for Constructive Solid Geometry. This means constructing a model through a combination of combining objects, subtracting objects, and intersecting objects.

### Factoid:

Since a .scad file is plain text, it occupies very little space, and you can use tools like diff effectively.

### Length 1:

Well, there isn't too much you can do with one character, but one very useful character is [the debug modifier](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Modifier_Characters#Debug_Modifier):

```
#
```

This character can be placed in front of any CSG tree to highlight it, even if it would be invisible in the final output (such as if the CSG object was subtracted from another object). I'm not allowed to write any more code to explain this, so I'll use pictures.

Without the modifier:

[image: No modifier]

With the modifier:

[image: With modifier]

(Image Source: OpenSCAD User Manual, Wikibooks, CC-BY-SA)

### Length 2:

In OpenSCAD, you can create simple animations. How, you ask? This is done using a special variable for animation:

```
$t
```

This variable repeatedly loops from 0 to 1, which your code can use to change the position of an object, rotate an object, or do pretty much anything when combined with control flow structures. OpenSCAD can dump png frames at user specified intervals to create videos and/or gifs.

Adding a *single line of code* to a program (in this case, one of the examples, which also happens to be the OpenSCAD logo), and running the output through a gif maker can turn it into an animation like this:
[image: Rotating OpenSCAD logo]

### Length 3:

There are a wealth of libraries in OpenSCAD, and one way to access them is via the command:

```
use
```

There are actually two commands with similar functionality, but the other one has too many bytes. The main difference is that any top-level code (code outside a function/module) isn't executed with `use`, while it is executed for the *other* command. Both commands must be placed before any use of imported functions.

There are a couple of widely used libraries (Note that some of these should be added to the project with the other command instead):

- [MCAD](https://github.com/SolidCode/MCAD)- this contains basic utilities (more shapes, gears, some math, etc), and often is installed automatically with OpenSCAD.
- [Write.scad](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:16193)- Many of it's functions have been superseded by built-in functions in OpenSCAD, but it allows you to do a little more than the built-in functions can do (write curved text, for example).
- [BOLTS](http://www.bolts-library.org/en/index.html)- This extensive library allows you to use standard hardware parts (and some non-standard hardware) in your projects.
- [The General Library of Relativity](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:349943)- Allows creating and positioning of objects relative to other objects.
- [String Theory](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:526023)- Made by the same person as Relativity, this provides various string utilities, along with regex functionality.

### Length 4:

4 bytes is in that weird range where you can't really show off special variables or 1-character modifiers, but it's too short to really demonstrate the usage of a keyword.

However, it is the smallest whole program that isn't empty (or made up of only whitespace and semicolons) that compiles/runs without an error:

```
a=1;
```

This just assigns 1 to the constant `a`. In OpenSCAD, almost everything is a constant within its scope. Recursion, iteration, and defining separate constants are two common ways to circumvent this limitation. Note that OpenSCAD is dynamically typed.

### Length 5:

Much of OpenSCAD's power comes from its conditional branching. Assuming that `a` is a boolean value, you can write:

```
if(a)
```

Alternatively, you can put in any expression that evaluates to a boolean. This may be followed by a single statement, or by a code block surrounded by braces. The `if` statement shouldn't be used to conditionally assign variables, however—Any variable re-assignment creates a scope for the new variable which effectively shadows, not replaces the original variable. Conditional variable assignment must be done on declaration of the variable, with the ternary operator.

### Length 6:

This one is really cool:

```
hull()
```

It's the digital equivalent of wrapping a piece of plastic wrap around an object:

Without hull:

[image: No hull]

With hull:

[image: Yes hull]

### Length 7:

This one isn't too exciting, but it is very useful:

```
[0:2:6]
```

This evaluates to an array. The first number is the starting value, the last number is the ending value, and the (optional) middle number is the step. For example, the previous line of code would evaluate to `[0,2,4,6]`. Arrays can be nested (jagged arrays and different levels of nesting are allowed) and they can be assigned to a variable.

### Length 8:

This is one of the three main CSG operations in OpenSCAD:

```
union(){
```

Now would be a good time to talk about the tree structures in OpenSCAD. In OpenSCAD, every object (in terms of 3D modeling, not OOP; OpenSCAD is definitely not OOP) is a node on a tree, and each can contain sub-trees.

Every OpenSCAD model is built from a handful of built-in [primitive objects](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Primitive_Solids) (these primarily act as end-nodes), and [various](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Transformations) built-in [operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/CSG_Modelling) (these typically contain their own sub-trees). Additionally, you can define your own operations that either transform their sub-trees, or create a model on its own—but that's a topic for later on.

Back to `union`: this operator wraps everything in its sub-tree into one node (but doesn't do anything to the objects themselves), so that they can be treated as one whole unit when used in other operations. It may not do much on its own, but when combined with other operations, it can be a vital tool.

### Length 9:

Here's a mouthful:

```
minkowski
```

The `minkowski` function involves taking the [minkowski sum](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Minkowski_sum_3/index.html) of an object. This one is a bit weird, as it is taking one shape, and moving it around the surface of another object. It's hard to explain in words, so an image is definitely helpful.

Non-summed:

[image: Not summed]

Summed:

[image: Summed]

The same process can also be extrapolated into the third dimension:

[image: 3D Non Summed]
[image: 3D Summed]

Note that when using this, it can take a while for it to render, especially for more complex objects.

### Length 10:

Here is another important CSG operation:

```
difference
```

This takes the first element of its sub-tree, and "subtracts" every other object in the sub-tree from it.

For example, in this picture, the cylinder is being subtracted from the cube. Note that the debug modifier is used to make the cylinder visible:

[image: Difference]

### Length 11:

Finally, there are enough bytes to be able to define a module:

```
module a(){
```

A module in OpenSCAD can define an object, operate on objects, or both. Everything (including the built-ins) that creates or modifies objects (not numbers, booleans, arrays, or strings, though; those are for functions, which I'll talk about in another section) is a module. The module can also accept variables (and define default values), though you have to be careful, as OpenSCAD is dynamically typed. Some modules can operate on their sub-trees; however, most modules won't do anything if they are passed a sub-tree. More info can be found [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/User-Defined_Functions_and_Modules#Modules).

### Length 12:

Finally, the third major CSG operation

```
intersection
```

This takes the intersection of two objects.

For example, the intersection of these two objects:

[image: Not Intersected]

would be:

[image: Intersected]

Note that intersection doesn't work as expected when working with for loops, but there is [a way around that](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Conditional_and_Iterator_Functions#Intersection_For_Loop). This may to change in future versions, however.

### Length 13:

Everything so far has been a yellow (or translucent red) color. How boring! You can spice it up with colors like "mediumspringgreen" and such, but since that would put this over the length limit, I'll choose a different color:

```
color("cyan")
```

As expected, this changes the color of its subtree:

[image: It's also "aqua"]

The `color` module accepts any of the standard [CSS/SVG color names](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color), and can also accept a vector of RGB colors (scaled from 0-1, *not* 0-255) with an optional transparency. More info on `color` [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Transformations#color).

### Length 14:

OpenSCAD includes the for loop, for simple iteration:

```
for(i=[0:2:8])
```

There are a couple finer points when dealing with for loops. For one, the loop variable can iterate over any array. As stated in the Length 7 snippet, `[0:2:8]` simply evaluates to `[0,2,4,6,8]` when looped through. Since OpenSCAD isn't type safe, make sure that the loop body can handle the loop effectively. Besides a special `for` loop for dealing with intersections, there are a couple variations that greatly expand the `for` loop's capability that I'll describe when there are more bytes.

### Length 15:

Adding to the list of built-in modules:

```
scale([x,y,z]){
```

(Note that `[x,y,z]` is a vector, which is basically an array in OpenSCAD. You can substitute the whole expression for a variable that equals a vector.) When applied to a sphere, you can do things like stretch it so it becomes a blimp-like shape:

[image: Blimp]

This command can be applied to any sub-tree and have a similar effect.

### Length 16:

```
resize([5,8,10])
```

This command takes the bounding box of the subtree, and stretches (or shrinks) each axis to fit in a new bounding box. For example, say you have a sphere of radius 10:

[image: Sphere]

If you resize it to a 5x8x10 bounding box, it becomes:

[image: Whatever this is]

### Length 17:

```
linear_extrude(h)
```

(where h means height)

If I take this 2D square (size 10x10):

[image: Square]

and I apply a linear extrude with a height of 5 to the square, then I get a rectangular prism:

[image: Rectangular prism]

### Length 18:

While you can't set arrays from inside a for loop (the variable inside the for loop shadows the variable in the wider scope), OpenSCAD compensates by adding list comprehensions.

```
[for(i=[1:10])i*2]
```

This list comprehension iterates i from 1 through 10, and for each value of i, the result is 2i. This expression results in the array `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]`. Note that this array could have been produced with `[2:2:20]`.

### Length 19:

```
import("model.stl");
```

(Note that STL is a file format for 3D models. It contains a triangular mesh of all of the surfaces in a model.)

If I save the hilbert cube model from [here](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:781532) as `model.stl` in the same folder as the .scad file, OpenSCAD allows you to use it as a component of the model (e.g. you can perform CSG operations on the model).

[image: Hilbert cube]

### Length 20:

Let's do some animation!

```
$vpr= [45,0,$t*360];
```

`$vpr` is a special variable in OpenSCAD. It contains the rotation of the viewport (`$vpt` and `$vpd` contain the translation and distance, respectively). If you assign them a new value, the viewport changes to that value.

As stated earlier, `$t` contains a value between 0 and 1.

To start with animation, click View > Animate. That will bring up a bar like this:

[image: Bar]

Time will automatically change when you configure the other two values. This becomes the value of $t.

Steps means the amount of steps that `$t` will go through between 0 and 1.

FPS is the amount of steps OpenSCAD will go through every second.

If "Dump Pictures" is selected, as OpenSCAD goes through the animation, it will save the pictures sequentially.

With the above code, 30 steps, and 10 FPS, I get this exciting animation:

[image: Super exciting]

Of course, you can use `$t` in other places as necessary.

Comment: Looks like a very interesting language; I'd love to see more. :)

Comment: I did not expect to see an OpenSCAD answer here, props!

Answer (score 27):

## Agda

#### Factoid:

Agda is a Haskell inspired language with even more advanced type system, that makes it possible to declare statements about programs and proof their validity. It comes with proof assistant tools, embedded into Emacs, so you can use it interactively to construct mathematical proofs.

#### 1

```
_
```

Underscore has bunch of meanings in Agda. It can mean a wildcard, meaning you don't care about naming stuff when you pattern match. It can tell Agda to guess values or types, which it does by solving type equations. Or as a placeholder in function definitions, it can be placed nearly anywhere, so that definition of post,pre,infix operators are possible (e.g. `_!` can define factorial and `if_then_else_` a condition clause).

#### 2

```
()
```

An absurd pattern. Doing a pattern match on an absurd pattern tells Agda, that this pattern is impossible. Or in other words, we trying to match to an empty type (bottom `⊥`), the type with no values.

#### 3

```
Set
```

Types and values in Agda are treated similarly. As value can be of a certain type, the type itself can be of a type of something, this something is called `Set`. For example `0 : ℕ : Set` means that zero has type of natural numbers (or just 0 is a natural number) and natural numbers are of type `Set` (or natural numbers represent type or set). But it doesn't end here, because even `Set` has type `Set₁`, which has type `Set₂` and all the way up to infinity (and beyond).

#### 4

`data` keyword is used to define types in Haskell's GADT (Generalized Algebraic Data Types) style. Here are some examples

Empty type

```
data ⊥ : Set where
```

Boolean type

```
data Bool : Set where
  false : Bool
  true : Bool
```

Natural numbers

```
data ℕ : Set where
  zero : ℕ
  suc : ℕ → ℕ
```

#### 5

```
f = f
```

Spaces around operators are mandatory, so we can only now construct some simple definition. This snippet is a valid definition of non-interrupting program in Haskell, but it won't compile in Agda due to the Termination check failure. Agda is a total language, meaning every program in it should terminate and there is no way to construct a valid non-terminating function. The reason behind it is that this function can be of an arbitrary type `f : ∀ A → A`, and due to Curry–Howard isomorphism between programs and proofs, constructing a value of any type basically means that we proved everything!

#### 6

```
record
```

Agda has records, datatypes with single constructor. For example we can define a pair like so

```
record Π (A B : Set) : Set where
  constructor _,_
  field
    first  : A
    second : B
```

And we can define pairs now `p = (zero , false)` (parenthesis can be omitted) and extract fields from them: `Π.first p` is `zero` and `Π.second p` is `false`.

Also there is a convention to define a type with one element as an empty record

```
record ⊤ : Set where
```

There is only one value of type `⊤`, which automatically deduced to be an empty record `record {}`, it can be used to define true propositions.

#### 7

```
∃ n = n
```

For an arbitrary type of `n` this is just an identity function, but if it has type for example `∃ : ℕ → ℕ` then it can be interpreted as a proof that natural numbers exist!

#### 8

```
λ n -> n
```

The same identity function can be written as an anonymous function (lambda). It can be written as a 7 length snippet with `→` instead of `->`, but I can't come up with a more interesting 8-snippet otherwise.

#### 9

```
λ x _ → x
```

This would be a definition of a constant function that returns its first argument and discards the second. A complete defintion with the most general type that works with argument types of any universe looks like this

```
const : ∀ {α β}
       → {A : Set α} {B : Set β}
       → (A → B → A)
const = λ x _ → x
```

Stuff inside curly brackets `{}` tells Agda that this variables are implicit and they should be decided based on the explicit variables `A` and `B`. It's possible to include them anyways like this `const {α} {β} {A} {B} x _ = x`.

#### 10

```
Th = ⊥ → ⊤
```

Here I defined a theorem `Th` : false implies true. I can prove it by constructing a value of type `Th`. As I mentioned earlier a true proposition `⊤` has only one value and it also represents an empty record and the proof would be just returning it

```
f→t : Th
f→t = λ _ → record {}
```

Similarly we can proof `⊤ → ⊤` or `∀ A → ⊤`, so basically anything implies true propositions. Contrary to false propositions, which can't be proven without constructing a value of empty type. We can proof `⊥ → ⊥` by absurd pattern and `⊤ → ⊥` can't be proven. Therefore a complete implication table in Agda is represented in following statements

```
f→t : ⊥ → ⊤
f→t = λ _ → record {} -- empty record

t→t : ⊤ → ⊤
t→t = f→t -- same proof

f→f : ⊥ → ⊥
f→f () -- absurd pattern

t→f : ⊤ → ⊥
t→f = {!!} -- nothing could be written here, just a hole
```

#### 11

```
¬ P = P → ⊥
```

The definition of propositional negation. You can look at it this way: if `¬ P` is true then `P` is false and therefore should imply false `⊥` (`P` also should be implied from false, but everything is implied from `⊥`). Given this definition it is possible to prove some theorems, like contradiction `A → ¬ A → B`, contraposition `(A → B) → (¬ B → ¬ A)`, double negation `A → ¬ (¬ A)` and `¬ (¬ (¬ A)) → ¬ A`. Note that Agda being an intuitionistic system, the double negation elimination `¬ (¬ A) → A` is not a theorem: *"It's not the case that it's not raining"* doesn't mean *"it's raining"*, but only that the *rain* would not be contradictory.

#### 12

Usually `in` is written as `∈`, but I'm short of one character

```
x in P = P x
```

Types of functions from type `A` to some `Set _` can be thought of as a usual set in maths sense, set membership therefore has type `_∈_ : ∀ {ℓ} → A → (A → Set ℓ) → Set _`. Empty set is then simply `∅ = λ _ → ⊥` and the universe (the set that contains every element of type `A`) is `U = λ _ → ⊤`. Other related definitions include

```
x ∉ P = ¬ x ∈ P
∁ P = λ x → x ∉ P -- complement set of P
P ⊆ Q = ∀ {x} → x ∈ P → x ∈ Q -- subset
```

#### 13

```
V A : ℕ → Set
```

This is a simplest data declaration for vectors (lists with size). The full definition with constructors looks something like this

```
data V A : ℕ → Set where
    []  : V A zero
    _∷_ : ∀ {n} → A → V A n → V A (succ n)
```

Notice that it's a dependent type, it depends on the value of type `ℕ`! Now the function like `head` which returns the first element of a vector can be defined without worrying about empty vector case, we just give it a type that works only with non-empty vectors like so

```
head : ∀ {n} → V A (succ n) → A
head (a ∷ as) = a
```

Comment: Wow! Where do I get a compiler / interpreter?

Comment: @cat [sure](https://github.com/agda/agda#installing-agda)

Answer (score 27):

## Befunge-98

(No love for my favorite language?)

Befunge is a 2D programming language operating on a toroidal space - the 'grid'. In addition to the normal operators (all of which are single ASCII characters), there are also special instructions that change the direction in which the instruction pointer moves through the grid. The language was designed to be as hard as possible to compile, to this end, it contains elements of self-modification.

There are two versions of Befunge: *Befunge-93*, the first version (which limits the grid size to 80x25 and, as such, is not Turing-complete); and *Befunge-98*, the [final specification](http://quadium.net/funge/spec98.html) (which allows unlimited grid size and much other useful functionality). In this post, I will use Befunge-98 for the code snippets because I feel it is the more useful of the two; a note will be included next to those snippets which are compatible with Befunge-93.

I recommend using [CCBI](https://deewiant.iki.fi/projects/ccbi/) to run longer code in Befunge-98. There are some other options for if you want to see Funge-space and the stack while the program is running: [this online Befunge-93 interpreter](http://www.bedroomlan.org/tools/befunge-93-playground) (with 'klunky' input), and [this online Befunge-98 interpreter](http://befungius.aurlien.net/) (with no input at all, though it runs fast).

### Snippets

#### Length 1 (Also works in Befunge-93)

```
.
```

Prints out 0, forever and ever and ever. Because Befunge's space is toroidal, the pointer wraps around when it encounters an edge. Befunge starts with an empty stack for its memory; trying to pop or do operations on an empty stack makes it 'generate' as many zeroes as needed for the operation.

#### Length 3 (Also works in Befunge-93)

```
&.@
```

(Still kind of a boring example, but less so.) This one accepts a decimal number (`&`) from stdin and prints it (`.`) to stdout. Then - aha, a new feature! - it terminates at the `@`. This is a pretty boring program, but you can only do so much with three characters...

#### Length 4 (Also works in Befunge-93)

```
1+:.
```

Another infinitely looping program. Each loop takes the top number on the stack and increments it, duplicates it (with `:`), and prints one of the duplicates, leaving the other on the stack for the next loop. (Since printing a number removes it from the stack, duplication is needed in order to keep a copy.) The result of this is a program that prints the positive integers, starting from 1.

#### Length 6 (Also works in Befunge-93)

```
8:*00p
```

Unless the user can watch Funge-space while the program is executing, this program appears to do nothing. In fact, it even *terminates*, rather than looping infinitely. "How?" you might ask. "You said before that the `@` operator ends the program, and there is no such thing here!" Here lies one of the most intriguing aspects of Befunge: the ability for the program to modify its own instruction space.

The `p` operator takes a number, let's call it *n*, and a coordinate pair *x, y* (in order such that *y* is on top of the stack), and puts the character with codepoint *n* in the Funge-space grid square at the given coordinates. In this case, it puts an `@` (ASCII value 64, or 8*8, or `8:*`) at position 0, 0 - the top-left corner of the program, where the `8` is initially. Then, wrapping around, the pointer hits the `@` it just set down and stops - the program has modified its own code. There is also a `g` operator that grabs the value of the character at the given coordinates; in this way, the program space can also be used as program memory that's more convenient than the stack.

Here's where Befunge starts to show its true colors! It's a cunning and devious language.

#### Length 7

```
~:a`j@,
```

Here we start seeing interesting constructions, and also some features that are not in Befunge-93. This program takes exactly one line of text and prints it out again - specifically, it keeps accepting characters from stdin (using `~`) and checking whether the character is greater than 10 (`a`, new to -98), the value of a newline. If it is, it prints; if not, it terminates. This is accomplished using `j` (also new to -98), our first control operator - which pops a value and jumps over that many instructions - in this case either 1 (if the character value is greater than 10) or 0 (if it is not).

#### Length 8

```
1#;::.+;
```

This introduces the `#` operator, or trampoline, which jumps the instruction pointer over the next symbol to execute - the same as `1j`. It originated in Befunge-93, due to [the necessity](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Wire-crossing_problem) of such an operator in a two-dimentional language. We can also see `;`, a 98-exclusive operator that also moves the pointer around - this one jumps it all the way to the next `;` along the direction the pointer is moving. Here it's used to create an infinite loop so the initial `1` only pushes a 1 at the beginning. The end result is a program that prints out, starting at 1, sequential powers of 2 forever and ever.

Comment: I feel your pain. I think this contest is over and my `awk` entry was just made too late.

Comment: I feel your pain too and upvoted you, if you're feeling kind you might watch my [Rebmu video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDKaz1iB9wQ) in return :-)

Comment: @Kasran You have 21 up-votes now. You could publish some pretty interesting things. Some ideas: random number generator, maze generator, maybe even a maze solver.

Answer (score 27):

## Lua

**Factoid**

Lua is a dynamic, lightweight yet powerful, highly portable (pure Ansi C), fast and easy to learn scripting language.
Initially designed to be a configuration language and to be embedded in applications to script them, it is also used as a glue between native libraries and to be a standalone language on its own.

**Length 1**

```
;
```

You will nearly never see a semi-colon at the end of a Lua statement (unless that's the taste of the coder!), as they are totally optional and, most of the time, unnecessary. They can be used if you want to put two statements on the same line (even then it is optional: `a = 5 b = 3` is OK (but ugly!)) and to avoid some ambiguity: `a = f (f1 or f2)(x)` can be seen as `a = f; (f1 or f2)(x)` or as `a = f(f1 or f2)(x)` (call of `f` with a function argument returns a function which is called with `x` as argument).
The semi-colon can be used as separator in table literals, too.

**Length 2**

```
..
```

That's the string concatenation operator in Lua. If we concatenate a number, it is converted to string. For something else than strings or numbers, the `__concat` metamethod is called (more on this later).

**Length 3**

```
nil
```

is a special value, whose main property is to be different from any other value... It is generally used to represent the absence of a useful value, equivalent to `null` in some other languages.
It is the only other value that is "falsy" (the first one being `false`, of course), any other value is coerced to `true` in a conditional expression.

**Length 4**

```
f's'
```

The function `f` is called with the literal string `"s"`. Note that literal strings can use single quotes or double quotes as delimiters.
Here, as a function called with a single, string argument, we can omit the parentheses. That's syntax sugar for `f('s')`. This can be used for writing some nice DSL.
This syntax shortcut can be used too when the single argument of the function is a table.

**Length 5**

```
a={1}
```

The variable `a` is assigned with a table with one entry, `1`.
Here, the table is treated as an array. We will see they can be also associative arrays (key / value).
Table is a fundamental data structure in Lua, so it is optimized and efficient: it can have both an array part (with fast numerical index access) and a hash part for the associative side.

**Length 6**

```
[[\n]]
```

A literal string (long format) made of two characters: backslash and n. The `[[ ]]` notation allows to write multi-line strings with no escapes inside. Newlines are kept literally (except the one immediately after the opening bracket, if any: it is ignored for convenience of formatting).
Lua allows nesting of long literal strings (eg. if you want to put one inside another) by putting a number of `=` sign between the two brackets. Of course, matching closing brackets must have the same number of equal signs.

**Length 7**

```
t={k=v}
```

A table defined as associative array: here, `k` is a shortcut for `['k']`, a string key (the latter annotation is useful for string keys that are not valid identifiers). `v` is a variable, its value will be the value of the entry.
The key (index) can be any Lua value, except `nil`. The value can be any Lua value, but `nil` actually removes the entry.
Access to entries can be done as `t.k` or as `t['k']`. The first form is valid only if the key is a valid identifier, otherwise we have to use the second form.

**Length 8**

```
a,b=f(x)
```

A function can return several values (put them after the `return` keyword, separated by commas), and these values can be assigned at once to several variables.
If the function provides more values than the number of left-hand variables, the extra values are dropped.
If it doesn't provide enough values, the extra variables get `nil` as value.
A common pattern in Lua is to return either a single value, or `nil` and an error message if something went wrong.

**Length 9**

```
--[[ C ]]
```

A block comment. Line comments are marked with a double dash. Block comments extends this notation with a block of text (potentially multiline) marked between double brackets. Actually, they use a syntax similar to long literal strings, including the equal signs between the brackets, whose number allows to distinguish nested blocks. This allows to avoid conflicts with other block comments or long literal strings when commenting out a long block of code.

**Length 10**

```
local v={}
```

Lua started its career as a configuration language, and is still useful as such. Because of this, its variables are global by default, ie. they are attached to the built-in `_ENV` variable and visible everywhere. That's also where we find the standard libraries, for example.
Of course, this global environment is to be avoided for most usages, because of collision risks, encapsulation issues, and because a global variable is slower than a local one.
Lua supports lexical scoping, we can define variables that are visible only within their scope, their chunk (from the declaration point to the end of the chunk) and the nested chunks.
The statement above declares a local variable initialized to an empty table.
For performance reason, a common practice is to bring global functions to the local scope, like `local print, find = print, string.find`.

**Length 11**

```
a,b,c=b,c,a
```

As seen, a function can return several values, which can be assigned in one go to several variables.
It also works with several values (separated by commas) on the right hand side.
The expression above cyclically permutes the values of a, b and c, ie. a takes the value of b which takes the value of c which is assigned the value of a. It is a variant of the `a, b = b, a` expression which swaps two values.

**Length 12**

```
::L:: goto L
```

The programming world frown upon the usage of GoTo, but the Lua authors consider it is malevolent only in bad hands... They introduced it in Lua 5.2 to answer a frequently asked feature: adding a `continue` statement. The `goto` statement effectively allows to jump to the end of a loop, and also allows to break out of several nested loops. Note that Java, which has `goto` in its reserved words, doesn't implement it, but have named `break` allowing such feature...
Here, `goto SomeName` jumps to a scoped label named... SomeName, which is defined by surrounding the name with double colons like `::SomeName::`

**Length 13**

```
(a or b){x=1}
```

This is a function call with a table as argument. Lua allows the syntax sugar of omitting the parentheses around the argument if it is unique and it is a table, similar to the call with a string seen at length 4. It allows to create some nice DSLs...
Here, we also see a logical expression between two functions: if `a` is defined, it is called with the argument. If it is not defined, ie. has the value `nil`, then that's `b` which is called (assuming it cannot be `nil`). This fallback syntax is idiomatic in Lua to provide default values to variables. It has the same function than the ternary operator of C-like languages (`a ? a : b`)
Note that in Lua, logical operators are spelled out: `or and not` instead of C's `|| && !`, slightly less readable for newbies.

**Length 14**

```
_ENV={p=print}
```

Starting from Lua 5.2, local environment of a current function is exposed using variable `_ENV`. While its default value is `_G`, global environment, as any other variable, it can be assigned any value!
Here, we change local environment, one from which free names are resolved, to table including single key-value pair with string key `p` and value being built-in function `print`. After this assignment, `p` will be the only resolvable name in current environment.

**Length 15**

```
ffi.load'mylib'
```

While Lua have official implementation in ANSI C, others exist as well. One of most well-known ones is [LuaJIT](https://luajit.org/download.html), in which this line would load C library called `mylib.so` on UNIX or `mylib.dll` on Windows and expose its functions directly to your Lua code. In addition to this, LuaJIT implements JIT-compilation for Lua code, greatly increasing its speed compared to official interpreter.
However, LuaJIT's  last release was back in 2017 and it also implements Lua 5.1 API, making its usage now somewhat questionable. Newer JIT compiler for Lua is [Ravi](https://ravilang.github.io/), that's based on LLVM and targets Lua 5.3 API. It also implements some language extensions.

**Length 16**

```
function N(a)end
```

You can create global functions with the `function` keyword followed by a name.

**Length 17**

```
N=function(a) end
```

The above snippet is syntactic sugar for this. `local function N()end` is sugar for `local N=function()end`. This is allowed because functions are first-class values.

**Length 18**

```
("n=%d"):format(3)
```

Wow, lots to introduce. This [`format`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.format)s the string `n=%d`, replacing the `%d` with the number 3. The `:` denotes a method call, which is the same as calling `("n=%d").format("n=%d", 3)`. But wait, `"n=%d"` doesn't have the property `format`! Instead, since it isn't a table and doesn't have this property, Lua looks at its *metatable*, the global `string` table, and finds the `format` property there. Metatables are kind of like prototypes in Javascript. It then calls the `string.format` function with `"n=%d"` and `3` as its arguments, and returns `"n=3"`.

Comment: As @Benjamin seems too busy to have time to update his entry, I take the liberty to start a new Lua entry, since it is allowed by the rules... I have some snippets ready, so vote up! ;-)

Comment: Wonderful, I didn't even know you could use `[[ ]]` for multiline strings in Lua. Lua is rather under-appreciated.

Comment: I love your answers and the information you added to each snippet. Please update, i want to see the other snippets :)

Answer (score 27):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

#### Factoid

Jelly is inspired by J and, in particular, its trains. Everything in Jelly – including literals – is a *link* (function), and you can combine several links by simply *chain*ing them together.

As a tacit language, Jelly programs usually do not require variable references. Also – like J – many of Jelly's *atoms* (built-in functions) vectorize automatically. This makes Jelly fairly competitive in code golf competitions.

#### Length 1

```
b
```

This full program is a neat little base conversion utility. It takes an integer **n** as left and a base **k** as right argument (resp., first and second command-line argument) and converts **n** to base **k**.

Now, since integer-to-base conversion only makes sense if both arguments are numbers, the atom `b` vectorizes with depth **0**, meaning that it "searches" for corresponding numbers in **b** and **k**.

For example, `[n1,n2] b [k1,k2]` converts **n<sub>1</sub>** to base **k<sub>1</sub>** and **n<sub>2</sub>** to base **k<sub>2</sub>**, while `[n3,n4] b k0` converts both **n<sub>3</sub>** and **n<sub>4</sub>** to base **k<sub>0</sub>**. Moreover, the list don't have to be rectangular. Combining the two previous examples, `[[n1,n2],[n3,n4]] b [[k1,k2],k0]` gives the same results as before.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Yg&input=&args=W1sxNywgMTNdLCBbMTIsIDE1XV0+W1s1LCAxMF0sIDJd)

#### Length 2

```
»\
```

Aside from atoms, Jelly has *quicks*. While a few of them are similar to atoms and simply execute some code, the vast majority affect the behavior of one or more atoms to their left.

For example `»` on its own is a dyadic atom that returns the maximum of two numbers. The quick `\` pops the link `»` from the current chain and pushes the *quicklink* `»\` in return, which performs a cumulative reduce by maximum, i.e., it computes the cumulative maxima of a list of numbers or characters.

For example, `[n1,n2,n3,n4] »\` computes **max(n<sub>1</sub>)**, **max(n<sub>1</sub>, n<sub>2</sub>)**, **max(n<sub>1</sub>, n<sub>2</sub>, n<sub>3</sub>)** and finally  **max(n<sub>1</sub>, n<sub>2</sub>, n<sub>3</sub>, n<sub>4</sub>)**, and returns the list of all four results.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wrtc&input=&args=JzEzMjcn)

#### Length 3

```
+×_
```

Any chain of links is parsed in a particular fashion, which depends both on the arities of the involved links (i.e., the number of arguments they expect) and the arity of the chain (i.e., the number of arguments passed to the chain).

If the above full program is executed with two arguments **a** and **b**, *sum*, *multiplication* and *difference* are all dyads, `+×_` becomes a dyadic *fork*; the outmost links are evaluated first, then the inner link is called on both results. In this particular example, the result is **(a + b) × (a - b) = a² - b²**.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=K8OXXw&input=&args=Nw+Ng)

If the program is executed with a single argument **c**, each of the links in `+×_` is a monadic *hook*, meaning that is gets called with te previous return value – initially the input argument – and the input argument. Our example thus computes **((c + c) × c) - c = 2c² - c**.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=K8OXXw&input=&args=Ng)

#### Length 4

```
’!²%
```

This full program – intended to be run with a positive integer (or a list of positive integers) as sole argument – is a primality test based on [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem), which states that an integer **n > 2** is prime if and only if **(n - 1)! ≡ -1 (mod n)**.

Since **(-1)² = 1** and **(n - 1)!** is divisible by **n** is **1** or composite, **((n - 1)!)² % n** is **1** if **n** is prime and **0** otherwise.

The code consists of three monadic atoms (*decrement*, *factorial*, *square*), which are parsed as *atops* (i.e., they are applied one after the other, each on top of the previous one), and the dyadic *modulus* – a hook – which gets called with the previous return value and the original **n** as left and right arguments.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCZIcKyJQ&input=&args=MSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNSwgNDI)

#### Length 5

```
“wat»
```

Jelly has built-in string compression. While it has a few limitations – only produces printable ASCII and only compresses dictionary words – it performs rather well under these conditions.

The characters between `“` and `»` are replaced with their indices in [Jelly's code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), which are then interpreted as the as digits of a bijective base-250 number. In turn, this number arithmetically encodes either an index in the dictionary of short or long words, or a single printable ASCII character.

All arbitrary sequences of Jelly's code page's characters decode to something; the example string `wat` is decodes to the following.

```
 stickup Aachen
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcd2F0wrs&input=)

To compress strings, you can use [this script by @Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70932/12012).

Comment: Where are the more snippets?

Answer (score 26):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/)

Created by Yukihiro "Matz" Matsumoto in 1995, Ruby is a dynamical object-oriented programming language. It's built/inspired by Perl, Smalltalk, Eiffel, Ada, and Lisp.

Matz, speaking on the Ruby-Talk mailing list, May 12th, 2000.

> Ruby is simple in appearance, but is very complex inside, just like our human body

**Factoid**
In Ruby  everything is objects, so no primitives. Parentheses are also optional. Opening up for some interesting coding, but that doesn't mean that you have to avoid them.
Is this really that readable?

`puts array.delete hash.fetch :foo`

**Snippet 1**
Use the `$` to create global variables, but don't clutter the namespace please.

**Snippet 2**
To create a new hash, all you need to type is `{}`.

**Snippet 3**
Ruby uses `nil` as a false value. So no need to do `var.nil?` everywhere.

**Snippet 4**
`puts` is used to print a string version of an object with a new line at the end. Short for "put string". Can also be shortened to just `p`.

**Snippet 5**
To make Ruby even more powerful it handles closures. And with the use of `f.call` you can call/invoke a block or function. Pretty sweet. For those unfamiliar with closures. A closure can pass it around like an object (to be called later). It also remembers the values of all the variables that were in scope when the function was created. It can access those variables when it is called even though they may no longer be in scope.

**Snippet 6**
The snippet `class C` returns nil, and that is because everything in Ruby has a return value. You can even return multiple values.

**Snippet 7**
With the use of `include` Ruby support single inheritance. Making it easy to mixin modules.

**Snippet 8**
`x||=true` is one of several logical operators that Ruby supports. This one checks if x has been defined, and if not sets it to true.

**Snippet 9**
`Fo.new(x)` calls the class `Fo` initialize function, with the value of `x`. There is no constructor in Ruby so you are free to return what value you like from the `.new()` call.

**Snippet 10**
As mentioned earlier Ruby supports multiple return values, and it is easily done with `return x,y`. The values are returned as they are read, and if you have more return values then what you have for assigning the rest will be dropped. Using the `*` on the last variable will make an array and assign the rest of the return values to that array.

**Snippet 11**
RubyGems is the packet manager for Ruby started in November, 2003. Original a stand alone program, but as of Ruby 1.9 it is a part of the standard library.
Use the code snippet `gem install` and the name of the package (for example 'sinatra') to install it.

**Snippet 12**
`[1,2]<<[3,4]` The command '<<' pushes or append a object to the array. In our case the array [3,4] will be pushed 'into' the array [1,2], making it 'look' like this [1,2,[3,4]]. So it does not merge two arrays.

**Snippet 13**
`x.map{|y|y+1}` The map function iterates over the array 'x' and invokes the block given, and returning a new array with the modified values. In our case it will iterate over the values in the array and increment them with one.

**Snippet 14**
`x.map!{|y|y+1}` This snippet is similar to the previous one, but calls on the function map!. The '!'/exclamation mark tells the user that this function will modify the object calling it, often called destructive or dangerous functions.

**Snippet 15**
The snippet `ARGV[0] ||false` checks if `ARGV[0]` evaluates to `true`, if not it will return the `or` value, false. `ARGV` is an array containing the arguments sent in at start time. `ruby app.rb test` will give you 'test' in `ARGV[0]`.

PS: Also check out this [post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/showcase-your-language-one-vote-at-a-time-experimental-challenge/44803#44803) about Ruby

Comment: 1 more upvote. `p` should be there I think

Answer (score 26):

### [μ-recursive functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-recursive_function)

These come in many flavors, but are all essentially the same: a "functional assembly" of sorts.

**Factoid**: μ-recursive functions are a Turing-complete model of computation that, unlike Lambda calculus (which is theoretically equivalent to it) has no more-or-less popular language based on it. Why? Because it manages to combine the readability of (((((Lisp)))))) with the eloquence of assembly. However, there are interpreters for several langauges that are actually flavors of μ. None of them, however, can operate with anything but unsigned integers. Pity.

μ, by default, supports only 2 datatypes - an unsigned integer and a function. Operators recieve and return functions, functions recieve and return unsigned integers. Simple and straightforward. That's all there is to the entire language.

If this recieves enough upvotes, I'll be providing snippets in **RF**, a small language based on μ-recursive functions created for educational purposes by a teacher at a university where some friends of mine study. It uses a flavor of μ that is a bit different from Kleene's. You can download it here: http://www.mediafire.com/download/fnsyze4crthgl89/rf_setup.rar (warning: entire interface is in Russian; function definitions go into the top text field, function calls go into the bottom left one, results get output to the bottom right one).

**Length 1 snippet:**

`N`

This is not runnable code, sadly. I'd need at least 5 upvotes for the first runnable RF snippet.

This is one of the 3 built-in functions supported by μ, the *successor function*. What does it do? Well, it simply takes one number as an input and returns this number + 1. It's also sometimes abbreviated as `s` in different μ languages.

**Length 3 snippet:**

`f()`

This is the shortest possible "input" call of a μ-recursive function. It calls a 0-ary (parameterless) function f with, well, no parameters.

As μ is a 100% pure functional language, input is restricted to function calls, and output is restricted to function return values. All μ-based languages, including RF, provide a way to list the function calls that the program should recieve as "input". Note that this specific example won't run in RF because it requires function calls to have a `;` at the end, but it could run in another μ-based language.

**Length 4 snippet:**

`M(O)`

This is one of μ's 3 operators: the minimisation operator, sometimes abbreviated as μ. Obviously, it gives the model of computation its name. This specific snippet *synthesizes* and returns a 0-ary function that always returns `0`.

Now, this calls for a little bit of theory.

What does this operator do? Its workings can be written concisely as follows:

`M(f(a1, a2, ... an-1, an)) called with arguments (a1, a2, ... an-1) returns the least value of an satisfying the condition f(a1, a2, ... an-1, an) == 0`

It takes an n-ary function `f` as input, and *synthesizes* and returns an `n-1`-ary function (i.e. taking one argument less than the input function).

What does the returned function do? When called with some arguments (`a1, a2, ... an-1`), it forwards them to the input function `f`. It then finds the least possible (i.e. starting from 0) value of the last argument (`an`) which, together with the forwarded arguments, will make `f` return `0`. If `f` doesn't ever return `0` in these conditions - hello, endless loop. If it does, the synthesized function returns the value of `an` it found.

In the snippet above, the operator takes the 1-ary built-in function `O`, and synthesizes a `1 - 1 = 0`-ary function which finds and returns the least value of the last (and, in this case, the first) argument that would make `O` return `0`. As `O` happens to *always* return `0`, the least value of the argument would be `0`. That is what the synthesized function will return.

Interesting note: there are two main different notation for this, as well as the other operators. Kleene, for example, uses a notation that is the inverse of the one RF uses: in his texts, `an` is actually the first argument of the input function `f`, not the last one. However, this doesn't really matter.

**Length 5 snippet:**

`O(1);`

I promised a runnable RF snippet, now, here you go. This is a RF function call "input". It calls the built-in 1-ary function `O` mentioned in the previous snippet, which always returns `0`, no matter what you pass to it. It can be really, really useful at times.

**Length 6 snippet:**

`I[1,2]`

This is the *identity* function, one of the 3 built-in functions. It can take several arguments and return one of them. It is defined as `I[i,n](a1, a2, ... an) = ai`

You can think of it as a function "template" of sorts. The square brackets can take 2 constant (nonzero unsigned integer) parameters, which determine the identity function's behaviour. The second parameter in the brackets is the number of the function's actual parameters. The first one is the index, starting from one, of the parameter that the function returns. For example, the function shown above can be read as follows: "define a function which takes 2 parameters and returns the 1st one".

**Length 7 snippet:**

`S(N,O);`

We finally reached another operator! `S` is the *superposition* operator. The piece of code above uses it to create an 1-ary function that always returns `1`.

This operator can be expressed as follows: `S(f0, f1,f2, ... fn) called with arguments (a1, a2, ... am) = f0(f1(a1, a2, ... am), f2(a1, a2, ... am), ... fn(a1, a2, ... am))`

At least 2 functions should be supplied to the operator. `f0`, the first function, should have an arity equal to the number of functions passed to the operator besides it (i.e. for `f1,f2, ... fn`, the arity of `f0` should be `n`). It cannot be a 0-ary function. All other functions passed to the operator should have an equal arity (i.e. `f1,f2, ... fn` should all have the arity `m`). The synthesized function shall also have this arity (`m`).

The synthesized function first calls all but the first of the operator's argument functions with the arguments passed to it, and then calls the first of the operator's argument functions with the others' return values and returns its result.

In the snippet above, for example, when we pass an argument to the created function, it calls `O` with this argument, which returns `0`. Then it calls `N` with this return value, which returns `0+1 = 1`, so the synthesized function also returns `1`.

**Length 8 snippet:**

`zo=M(O);`

This is a function definition! You can call it with `zo();`. It defines the zero-arity (parameterless) function returning `0` that I already discussed above.

Now we're getting to the fun part, recursion!

**Length 15 snippet:**

`f=R(zo,I[2,2]);`

Here `zo` is the previously defined (length 8 snippet) function.

`R` is the *recursion* operator. The above snippet defines a recursive function that takes one input parameter, decrements it until it reaches zero, then returns zero.

This operator can be expressed as follows: `f = S(f0, f1) called with arguments (a1, a2, ...a{m-1}, am) = if am > 0: f1(a1, a2, ... a{m-1}, am - 1, f(a1, a2, ... a{m-1}, am - 1)); if am == 0: f0(a1, a2, ... a{m-1})`.

This is basically good old tail recursion, plain and simple.

Let's see how the function above works for a parameter `x`: first, we have `f(x)`. If `x > 0`, we return `I[2,2](x - 1, f(x - 1))`, which is the same as `f(x - 1)`, and so on until we reach `f(0)`, in which case we return `zo()`, i.e. `0`.

The recursion operator is very important in μ-recursive functions, it's the backbone of most of the logic. However, some of its uses may seem a bit strange:

**Length 16 snippet:**

`de=R(zo,I[1,2]);`

This function takes one parameter `x` and returns `x - 1` (decrements), if `x > 0`, and returns `0` if `x == 0`. Implementing it as a counterpart to `N` is instrumental in implementing subtraction (just as `N` is necessary in addition).

This use of the recursion operator may be considered strange because, well, there's actually no recursion going on here at all! Consider: if `x > 0`, `de(x) = I[1,2](x-1, de(x-1))`, equivalent to simply `x-1`, so the tail call `de(x-1)` doesn't even happen! And if `x == 0`, it simply returns `zo()`, or `0`.

**Length 18 snippet:**

`de3p=S(de,I[3,3]);`

I see we didn't have an example for the superposition operator already, but here we go now. This defines a function `de3p` which, using the previously-defined `de`, takes 3 parameters and decrements the last one (calling it as `de(I[3,3](x,y,z)) = de(z)`, where `x`, `y` and `z` are the 3 parameters).

Using this function, we can now define subtraction!

**Length 19 snippet:**

`sub=R(I[1,1],de3p);`

The `sub` function takes two parameters, `x` and `y`, and returns `x - y`. How it does that is quite obvious: if `y > 0`, `sub(x,y) = de3p(x,y-1,sub(x,y-1)) = sub(x,y-1) - 1`. And if `y == 0`, `sub(x,y) = I[1,1](x) = x`. So, basically, the function calls itself until `y` is `0`, then takes `x` and backtracks for `y` steps, subtracting `1` from `x` on every step, resulting in `x - y`.

**Length 20 snippet:**

`next3p=S(N,I[3,3]);`

I decided to show a runnable example with every built-in function and operator; this is the last one, the built-in function `N`. This defines a function `next3p`, which takes 3 parameters and increments the last one by `1`: `next3p(x,y,z) = z + 1`. This is pretty much by analogy with the previous example and doesn't really need an explanation.

Now, using this example, we can do addition!

**Length 21 snippet:**

`ad=R(I[1,1],next3p);`

This defines a function `ad` which takes 2 parameters and adds them together. It works the exact same way as the subtraction function, the only difference being that `1` is added to `x` on every backtracking step.

Comment: can you show how would it be possible to subtract one from an input, or check for equality?

Comment: lots of upvotes! please update?

Comment: @proudhaskeller: I added examples for recursion, decrementing, subtracting and adding. Checking for equality is more verbose, but a simple way to check if `x==y` is to subtract `x` from `y`, then `y` from `x`, then sum the results: if the final result is `0`, the two numbers are equal, if it's not, they're not equal (using the defs in the answer, it'll be something like `eq=S(ad,S(sub,I[1,2],I[2,2]),S(sub,I[2,2],I[1,2]));`).

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ: I updated the answer with some new examples.

Comment: Cool! Just checking if I understood correctly: `b=R(O(O),S(N,S(O,I[1,2])));` is a function that returns `0` on `0` and `1` on everything else.

Comment: Fascinating. This is some beautiful stuff

Comment: @proudhaskeller: if you mean `M(O)` instead of `O(O)`, then yes, it should and does work (although not in the interpreter version linked above, as it doesn't allow nested `M(f)` operator calls because of a bug, you'd need to define `zo=M(O);` and use it instead).

Comment: @Mints97 but why shouldn't this work? `O` is a one ary function returning `0`, so I apply it to something and get zero. Or is `O`'s input should be of some specific type?

Comment: @proudhaskeller: ok, now remember this: the first argument to R should have an arity that's one less than the desired synthesized function. Your desired function has an arity of 1, as the second argument has an arity of 2. This means that the first argument to R should have an arity of 0 to match the second one. And `O(O)` would have an arity of 1, and wouldn't work even if this syntax was legal - except that it isn't, and `O(O)` should be expressed as `S(O,O)`.

Answer (score 26):

## Awk

### Factoid

Awk is a pithy programming language oriented toward string manipulation that also happens to be part of the POSIX standard set of utilities. Awk is named after its original authors, Alfred Aho, Peter Weinberger, and Brian Kernighan. Awk is often used in a pipeline, but [large programs have been written in it](https://web.archive.org/web/20230128221202/https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?doi=bc9360202eee91cc204b44345f7903310b94f983) (pdf, 127KB), too.

### 0 Characters

Nothing in life is free: an empty awk program prints nothing and exits successfully. (And seems to be the only awk program that doesn't read standard input.)

### 1 Character

```
1
```

An awk program consists of patterns and actions. Omit the action and awk assumes `{ print }`. The above pattern is always true, so `awk` behaves exactly like `cat`.

Divergence: Some versions of `awk`, such as [Kernighan's One True Awk](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Ebwk/btl.mirror/) consider both the empty string input and the always-true pattern illegal. [POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_01)

> Either the pattern or the action (including the enclosing brace characters) can be omitted.

So it comes down to whether or not `1` can be considered a pattern.

I'll try to rationalize the divergence between different versions of awk as long as I get more upvotes.

### 2 Characters

```
$3
```

The above pattern is true if the third field has value. If it does, awk will print the whole line. Thus, as a whole awk program, the above will filter all lines that have fewer than three fields.

Once again, the One True Awk does not consider `$3` a pattern.

### 3 Characters

```
int
```

BSD treats the above as `int($0)` and prints every line that can evaluate to a nonzero integer.

Most other awks I tried, including GNU awk consider this invalid. POSIX categorizes `int` as an [arithmetic function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_12) and says what it does when invoked without parentheses is undefined.

### 4 Characters

```
NF<4
```

This pattern causes Awk to print those records that have fewer than four fields in them. All editions of awk I tested behave consistently.

### 5 Characters

```
/foo/
```

Boring though it may be, it's time to introduce actual regular expressions. This one will match any line containing the string `"foo"`. This is Awk's bread and butter, and also why it's fairly unnecessary to combine awk and grep.

### 6 Characters

```
$NF=NR
```

This expression overloads the assignment operator `=` and assigns the number of the current record (row) to the last field. Treating assignments as booleans has the same caveats you might expect from another language. For example `$NF=NF` would set the last field value to the number of fields, but would skip empty rows.

### 7 Characters

```
!(NR%2)
```

Will print out every other row. It will print the odd ones. I could have written `NR%2==0` in the same number of characters, which is more flexible because I could also write `NR%2==1` to get the complementary set of rows. I just picked the most obscure syntax because code golf.

### 8 Characters

```
!s[$0]++
```

is one of my favorite Awk expressions. The first time it sees a line it prints it. It never prints the same series of characters again. It's the tersest stable, sort-free `uniq` I know.

### 9 Characters

```
{print$3}
```

Print the third column. This is one of those boring, but important, Awk "fundamentals" that hopefully opens the door for cooler things with more characters. It's also our first *action*. (Remember from *1 Character* that Awk programs are made up of series of patterns and actions.) Everything heretofore has been just patterns.

### 13 Characters

```
FNR<3{print}
```

Prints the top 2 lines of each file argument.  Obviously the `print` command is redundant, but there were already examples of shorter code. `FNR` is the line/record number of the current file; whereas `NR` represents the total number of lines/records processed from all files.

### 14 Characters

```
BEGIN{FS=","}
```

The `BEGIN` pattern is true before any files have been processed. `FS` is the field separator pattern used to divide a line/record into fields. This line assigns the field separator before the first file is processed.  It is equivalent to executing a script with the command-line argument of `-F,` with the benefit of not being required to remember to add the argument when running the script.

### 15 Characters

```
END{print FNR}
```

Prints the number of lines/records in the last file read. The `END` pattern is true after all input has been read, similar to `wc -l`

Comment: An even shorter way to do `{print$3}` (9c) is `$0=$3` (5c), which has the added benefit of not printing blank lines when there is no third column.  It also won't print when that third column is numerically zero; to do that, convert it into a string via `$0=$3""` (7c).

Comment: @AdamKatz Just assigning `$0=$3` isn't enough to print it. You also need a nonzero label, e.g. `{$0=$3}1` which is 8 characters, and there's already an 8 character answer. :( Oops... I see what you were getting at. You are using $0=$3 as the label. Nice.

Comment: @RobertBenson – Yup! `echo "1\n2\n3 4 5\n6 7 0 9\n10" |awk '$0=$3""'` will give you `5` and `0` (using mawk 1.3.3)

Comment: The 13c option could merely be `FNR<3` (5c).  I'm not sure why the 15c item uses `FNR` to count just the last file. Why not use `NR` and count the whole thing (like the total in `wc -l` but without the breakdown)? That would make it a 14 char example (which is far better than the current 14c example which is 11c more than `-F,`). (The per-file breakdown would require 80 chars: `NR!=FNR{print --NR,f;t+=NR;NR=1}{f=FILENAME}END{print FNR,f;print t+FNR,"total"}`)

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer as long as it's in the spirit of the "question". (IOW this isn't a code golfing challenge.) Some longer awk would be interesting.

Comment: #8 is pure genius! VERY usefull for exemple: to summarize a million-lines long cronjob email and see *in order* the gist of what happened.

Comment: The 2 character snippet `$3` won't print a line with 3+ arguments if the 3rd one is `0`.  Just an odd edge case to note. :)

Comment: And Re: the `$0=$3` alternative mentioned in a previous comment... One neat trick for forcing lines to print even if `$3` is zero is to use this pattern `1,$0=$3`.  Meaning AWK (or GAWK at least) will allow `expression,expression` in some places and if the first one is truthy the code will be executed.

Answer (score 26):

## Swift

### Factoid

Swift is a compiled language created by Apple, introduced in 2014 and is meant to replace Objective-C, the first supported language for OSX and iOS. Swift is currently used for iOS, macOS, tvOS and watchOS development. It uses the **[LLVM Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM)**

It focuses on writing less code (compared to Objective-C, which is very verbose) and handling safer types.
It features type inference, first-class type functions, closures, optional types, enum associated values and many more.

Swift is REPL, you can make your own idea by trying it on <del>http://swiftstub.com/</del>, or <del>http://www.runswiftlang.com</del> (these sites were shut down), use <del>https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl</del> instead.
Sites keep being closed, use https://www.weheartswift.com/swift-sandbox/.

### Snippets:

### • *14*

```
case let(8,x):
```

In a switch case, this statement is absolutely correct.
That switch must have a tuple with two values. When evaluating the expression, if the first value is `8`, it enters the case and fills the `x` variable with the second value of the tuple so you can access it directly inside the case.

### • *11*

```
/** #YES */
```

In Swift 2.0, comments can be written in Markdown. This produces a big title with **YES** as text. It can be displayed with format in the help navigator or quick help in Xcode.

### • *10*

```
var i=10e8
```

It creates a double value with `1000000000.0` in it. You can even write it like this `1_000_000_000.0`. Swift accepts different number notations for scientific or currency purposes. It all leads to the same value in memory, but helps to clarify source code.

### • *9*

```
f(#i:int)
```

When declaring a function, you have to name the formal and the actual parameter, but sometimes the actual parameter name is already a good formal parameter name. Instead of writing the name twice at declaration `func myFunc(aMarvelousInt aMarvelousInt: int)` you put a hash symbol in front of the parameter `func myFunc(#aMarvelousInt: int)`.
This feature has been removed from Swift 2.0 because it's the default behavior. To prevent using the variable name as a method label, insert an underscore and a space before the variable name `func myFunc(_ aMarvelousInt: int)`

### • *8*

```
Array<T>
```

Swift have generics, you can only insert objects of the specified type. The short notation of that array is `[T]`. In case you want to insert different types in an array, you must specify the type `AnyObject`, or `Any` if you don't insert `NSObject`s inside.

### • *7*

```
let π=3
```

This declares a constant `π` containing a approximation of pi. In Swift, source code is in **Unicode**. Your variable names can even contain emojis .

### • *6*

```
"\(i)"
```

This returns a `String` with the value of `i` in it. The backslash escape character followed by a value in parentheses evaluates the content and inserts it in the string, or if it's a `printable` object, it uses its `description`.

### • *5*

```
(3,7)
```

This is a tuple with two integers. Tuples can be used to make functions return several values. To get the values, you specify the index. `(3,7).1` returns `7`. You can also name the values at declaration and access them with an identifier. `(hours: 12, minutes: 46, meridiem: "PM").minutes` returns `46`.

### • *4*

```
func
```

That's the way to declare functions. A function is a first class object.

### • *3*

```
let
```

That's the way you declare constants. Constants have an optimisation in the compilation phase compared to the `var` declarations. An example is `let hoursInADay = 24.0`. Type inference makes that constant a `Double`.

### • *2*

```
..
```

This was the operator for half opened range in Swift 1.0, but to avoid ambiguity with the closed range operator `...`, it has been replaced with `..<` in Swift 1.1

You can use them in for loops (`for x in 0..<5`), on in switch cases (`case (0..<5): break`)

### • *1*

```
;
```

All Semicolons are facultative, until you put more than one instruction in a line.

Comment: I didn't realize that Swift is a compiled language. Is it JIT compiled?

Comment: I think it's not JIT compiled.

Comment: Huh. Looks like you're right. For some reason I thought it was either JIT compiled or interpreted. Whatever. +1 from me the other day, keep 'em coming!

Comment: @AlexA. It really looks like an interpreted language!  For a long time, whenever I saw Swift code I'd think "This code will be slow," even though Swift is very fast.

Comment: In fact, Swift has a JIT compiler so you can use it as a scripting language, but initially it's designed to have static typing.

Answer (score 26):

## dc

Almost nine months later -- I can't believe **dc** is not on the list!

#### Factoid

dc (**d**esktop **c**alculator) is a Unix utility older than the C programming language, and also the hardest programming language to [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=dc). Luckily it's probably preinstalled on your Linux, Unix or Mac box, and available for Cygwin too!

#### Length 1

```
1
```

dc is a stack oriented language. `1` is an instruction that pushes the number 1 one the stack so that we can use it for other instructions.

#### Length 2

```
?f
```

These *two* characters is a whole dc program that actually does *three* things! It takes a line of input, evaluates the input as dc code, and prints the contents of the stack afterwards. You can feed it with the next snippet that I will post if I get another vote :)

#### Length 3

```
zzp
```

`z` pushes the current stack depth. Initially the stack is empty, so `0` is pushed on the stack. The stack is then 1 deep, so the next `z` pushes `1`. `p` prints the top of the stack, which at this point is `1` (although the stack depth is now 2 :D).

#### Length 4

```
1A0F
```

dc supports number input to be in any base from 2 to 16, so the characters `0123456789ABCDEF` all work as digits. Input numbers are *not* limited to only digits found in the current radix, but they still respect the positions of that base. This means that in base 10 (which is the default), the given snippet evaluates to
 `1*10^3 + A*10^2 + 0*10^1 + F*10^0` = `2015` :)

#### Length 5

```
O[P]x
```

A convoluted way of printing a newline! `O` pushes the current *output* radix (which defaults to 10 and is independent of the input radix). `[]` defines a *macro* and pushes it. `x` pops the macro and executes it. `P` pops and prints a value as a byte stream.

#### Length 6

```
[dx]dx
```

Duplicate and execute, duplicate and execute, rinse and repeat. One copy of the macro is always left on the stack, so this loops forever. On some systems or implementations it may crash.

#### Length 7

```
[]sf7>f
```

This is sort of an if-statement: It will execute the empty `[`macro`]`, which is first `s`tored in register `f`, if the top of the stack is *less* than 7. Intuitive, huh? Just wait for an if-else! I will need way more characters for that though ;)

#### Length 8

```
3812649P
```

Prints a smiling face `:-)` Another example of the `P` command. 3812649 is the character points of the smiley string shifted to their correct position in base 256 and added together. Very useful technique for creating quines and quine-like programs.

#### Length 9

```
[9<L]dsLx
```

This is kinda the standard template for a loop -- `9` can be replaced with any code, and you can use other comparisons than `<`. As the snippet stands now though, it is perhaps not the most useful thing in the world:

The comparison consumes one element in addition to the 9 that is pushed every time, so the snippet will pop each element down to, and including, the first element which is less than or equal to 9. If it were to empty the stack, the last comparison would fail with a warning, and leave the 9 on the stack.

#### Length 10

```
6581840dnP
```

If I had actually counted how few characters it takes beforehand, I guess I wouldn't have ruined the surprise just two snippets ago, but yeah... this is a quine.
<sub><sup>(That means that the program prints out its own source code)</sup></sub>

#### Length 11

I just came up with this for the [dc golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84327/4372) post, and I'm quite excited because I'm absolutely sure that this is the shortest possible way to write an **if-else-statement**!

Suppose you want to do *if top-of-stack == `(THAT)` then `(THEN)` else `(ELSE)`*

```
[[(THEN)2Q]sI(THAT)=I(ELSE)]x
```

Uses the `I` register. The placeholders *(THAT)*, *(THEN)* and *(ELSE)* isn't part of the byte count, and `=` can of course be exchanged with any of  `>`, `!>`, `<`, `!<`, `!=`.

Answer (score 25):

## Groovy

#### Length 17 snippet

`import bob as Bob`

An import alias. No need for fully qualified names on name clash.

#### Length 16

`@CompileStatic()`

Another AST. Since it's a dynamic a language, Groovy may run slightly slower than Java. This isn't usually a problem, specially when working with databases and network, but bottlenecks may happen. Enter `@CompileStatic`. This AST walks the tree representation and makes every call a more pure bytecode call, giving [Java-like performance](http://objectscape.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/groovy-20-performance-compared-to-java.html) to your Groovy code. Here only Extensions and AST metaprogramming work. You can add it to a class and have it fully statically compiled, and have a single method of this class being dynamic using `@CompileStatic(SKIP)`.

#### Length 15 snippet

No ideas.

#### Length 14 snippet

`{}.setDelegate`

Every statement written inside a closure bears an interesting property: you can change the object which will respond to them. Also you can set the resolving order of responding objects. The topic is lengthy and i won't go over details, but this is possible:

```
c = {
    gimme "wot!"
}

c.delegate = new Expando(gimme: { it }) // this guy will answer the 'gimme' call
c.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST

assert c() == "wot!"
```

#### Length 13 snippet

`s ==~ /^echo/`

This snippet shows the (unofficially named) dynamite operator and a variant on string declarations. Groovy has a lot of ways to declare strings; `'simple-quoted strings'`, `"double-quoted-with-interpolation-string"`, `"""multi-line string"""` and what not. But those two stand over the crowd when it comes to regex: `/slashy string/` and `$/dollar-slashy-string/$`. No need to escape stuff, yey: `/\d+/`!

#### Length 12 snippet

`@TypeChecked`

This is an AST Transformation. It walks on the class/method where it is annotated and checks for typing errors. Groovy was born as a pure dynamic language, although you could add types to method params and return. Later on, a lot of people coming from a Java background felt the terseness of Groovy was great, but the dynamic typing was not so, thus `@TypeChecked` was born. It will still allow Groovy's neat syntax, extensions and other compile-time metaprogramming to occur, but it will report errors on stuff unknown at compile-time.

#### Length 11 snippet

`10.0 * 12.0`

Oh, a mere float multiplication, you say? O noes. A digit-dot-digit in Groovy defaults to a BigDecimal, for arbitrary precision calculation. A must for financial calculations. Since operators are only allowed in Java using primitives (and something in String), using a lot of BigDecimals in Java can get messy; this snippet can be written in Java as `new BigDecimal("10").multiply(new BigDecimal("20"))`. For floats, add an `f`: `10.0f`, a `d` for double, a `g` for BigInteger, and a lot more.

#### Length 10 snippet

`.metaClass`

Every object in Groovy has this little property which is responsible for keeping up the MOP (Meta Object Protocol), which allows Groovy's metaprogramming: we can add methods, properties and even mix entires classes one into another to add functionality. It really shines when you are working on pure dynamic Groovy, but it is not limited to.

#### Length 9 snippet

`a?.b?.c.d`

The safe navigation operator. It stop navigating on objects which might be null. This won't throw a `NullPointerException` if `a` or `b` are null, but `c` must not be null.

#### Length 8 snippet

`"a".tr()`

The `a` object is a `java.lang.String`, but [`tr`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#tr%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is not a method on Java's String. So what is going on here? Groovy features an Extension Mechanism. When the runtime finds an extension declaration in the classpath, it is automagically added to classes to enhance them. Extensions are statically compilable.

#### Length 7 snippet

`[:]+[:]`

Although the term is on pretty gray area, Groovy is a strongly typed language; the runtime makes little or no conversions between types. This snippet is really calling a well-defined method, which you can override, if needed. It can be understood pretty much as `new HashMap().plus(new HashMap())`

#### Length 6 snippet

`a b {}`

This snippet is parsed differently from snippet 5; from right to left. A method `a` receives the result of a method `b` receiving a closure/lambda as a param. Curly brackets `{}` is a closure/lambda/function, in Groovy.

#### Length 5 snippet

`u w m`

We can omit a lot of punctuation, as long as we remember Groovy's parsing order. This snippet is understood as `u(w).getM()`.

#### Length 4 snippet

`a*.b`

The *spread dot* allows calling a method, or getting a property, from any iterable. This snippet is collecting the property `b` from every object in the list `a` (assuming it is a list).

#### Length 3 snippet

`<=>`

The spaceship operator! Calling this is akin to calling the `compareTo` method. Also [chainable with Elvis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047936/how-do-i-chain-groovys-spaceship-operator-for-multilevel-sorting): `price <=> other.price ?: name <=> other.name`

#### Length 2 snippet

`?:`

The Elvis operator (tilt your head sideways to see it ;-) ). Every class has an `asBoolean()` method. Elvis calls it (in a deep mississipi voice) and, when true, returns the value, otherwise, the `else` part. Checking an empty list? Easy: `list ?: [1, 2, 3]`

#### Length 1 snippet

`&`

An `and` operator. Groovy supports operator overload, but in a slightly safer way: they are overloaded through their names and only a subset of them is available. You can overload the `&` operator by implementing a method called `and(param)` in your class.

#### Factoid

Groovy is an alternative JVM language. It features [AST Transformations](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compile-time+Metaprogramming+-+AST+Transformations), i.e., it is possible to walk the tree representation of the code and make whatever changes you'd like to it.

Comment: Needs more `?.` since that is just the best thing ever. Well, perhaps after Elvis, which you've already got.

Answer (score 25):

## Rebol

All the examples below work verbatim in **Rebol 3**.  Just type them into the Rebol 3 console (REPL) and see an immediate result.   Obviously for example *14*, if `file.txt` isn't present then it will throw an immediate error :)

#### 25

```
find "foobar & baz" "bar"
```

This returns - `"bar & baz"`

[`find`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/find.html) works on a [series](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/concepts/series-functions.html) returning either a series where it matches or `none` if no match was found.

Some other examples:

```
find "foobar & baz" "boo"              ; none
find ["foobar" "bar" "baz"] "bar"      ; ["bar" "baz"]
```

#### 24

```
random/only words-of lib
```

This returns a random word from the Rebol lexicon :)

`lib` is an object containing all the words defined by Rebol and also any created when importing modules.  [`words-of`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/words-of.html) returns a list of all the words within an [object](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/object.html). [`random/only`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/random.html) then picks one word at random from this list.

#### 23

```
f: function [n] [n * 2]
```

This creates a new function called `f` which takes one argument and doubles the value received (the last expression evaluated is automatically returned by the function).

There are a few different function generators in Rebol to choose from. For eg:

- [`function`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/function.html) - all variables created within block are local
- [`func`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/func.html) - all local variables must be declared with `/local` refinement
- [`does`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/does.html) - has no arguments or local variables.

See [Functions](http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-9.html) chapter from the [Rebol/Core User Guide](http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore.html) for more info.

#### 22

```
reduce [1 + 2 * 3 red]
```

The [`reduce`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/reduce.html) function  [evaluates](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/guide/code-eval.html) multiple expressions and returns a block of results.  There are two *expressions* in the above block so it returns a block with two values: `[9 255.0.0]`

NB. For the eagled eyed who were expecting `7` from `1 + 2 * 3` this is because Rebol has no operator precedence and simply [evaluates operators from left to right](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/concepts/math-precedence.html).  Use parenthesis to enforce precedence, for eg. `1 + (2 * 3)` would return `7`.

#### 21

```
compose [blue (blue)]
```

This returns a block with `[blue 0.0.255]`

The [`compose`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/compose.html) function evaluates any code found in parenthesis ([paren! datatype](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/paren.html)) but leaves everything else untouched.

#### 20

```
red + blue = magenta
```

This returns `true` because Rebol supports [tuple arithmetic](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/tuple.html#section-4).

#### 19

```
type? baz@email.com
```

Use [`type?`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/type-q.html) to find the value's datatype.  This example returns [`email!`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/email.html)

NB. As you can see from the examples so far, Rebol comes with a lot of handy [`datatypes`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes.html)

#### 18

```
$0.1 + $0.2 = $0.3
```

The above returns `true` because these are [`money!`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/money.html) datatypes. So ideal for [high precision arithmetic](https://github.com/gchiu/rebol.net/blob/master/wikipedia/Money.wiki) <s>[original link down at moment](http://www.rebol.net/wiki/Money)</s> .

#### 17

```
<div class="red">
```

This is a [`tag!`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/tag.html) datatype.

#### 16

```
24:00 - now/time
```

This returns how long there is left in the day (in HH:MM:SS - a [`time!`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/time.html) datatype).

NB. This code shows the first example of a [`refinement!`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/refinement.html) in Rebol.  With refinements you can modify the functions behaviour including adding extra arguments.  By itself  [`now`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/now.html) would return the current date and time (`date!`).  The `/time` refinement causes `now` to return the time only (`time!`).

#### 15

```
{"a" {foo} "c"}
```

This is one way to represent a [`string!`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/string.html) datatype in Rebol.   Another way to express this would look like this `"^"a^" {foo} ^"c^""` which isn't as visually appealing!

NB. Using braces over double quotes allows spanning of multiple lines and also nested `{}`.  The `^` is used to escape the *quoting* delimiter. So  `{closing brace is ^} opening brace is ^{}` would be how an unbalanced `{}` would look.

#### 14

```
read %file.txt
```

This will read in the entire contents of `file.txt` into memory.  Any word prefixed with `%` is a platform-independent [`file!`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/file.html) datatype.

NB. [`read`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/read.html) can also suck content down from other sources, eg. `read http://www.rebol.com` (this is a [`url!`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/url.html) datatype).

#### 13

```
100'000'000.0
```

This is the same as `100000000.0`.  Single quotes (`'`) are allowed to split up numbers for readability.

NB. Commas can also be used to mark decimal places, eg. `100'000'000,0` is a valid [`decimal!`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/decimal.html) datatype.

#### 12

```
something: 1
```

This sets the word `something` to represent the value 1.

NB. Rebol is quite liberal in what can be used for a word as long as it doesn't clash with any known datatype.  For e.g. another valid 12 length answer would be `a-.+!&'*?: 1`

#### 11

```
12-Dec-2012
```

This is a [`date!`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/date.html) datatype.

#### 10

```
to-hex red
```

Functions in Rebol have fixed arity.  The [`to-hex`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/to-hex.html) function expects one argument and returns a hex [`issue!`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/issue.html) datatype.

NB. The example given returns `#FF0000` which is ideal for CSS colours.

#### 9

```
#{FF0000}
```

This is hex (base-16) literal notation.  Other bases for this [`binary!`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/binary.html) datatype are also available.

#### 8

```
12:15:33
```

This is a [`time!`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/time.html) datatype (HH:MM:SS).

#### 7

```
newline
```

Gives Rebol's internal (platform-independent) newline character. Written as a character literal, this would be `#"^/"` -- the line-feed character.

NB. The `#` prefix here denotes a single character and not a string (ie. a series of characters like `"foobar"`).  And the `^/` is Rebol way of representing the [control code](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/char.html) for LF.

#### 6

```
speed?
```

Returns simplistic (and approximate) speed benchmarks for evaluation, CPU, memory & file IO.  Handy for comparing the speed of your Rebol on different machines.

NB. General convention is that postfixing word with `?` is used to signify *what's* / *what is its*.   For eg. `length? list` or `type? word`

#### 5

```
1 = 1
```

Equality test.

The operator `=` is infix synonym for [`equal?`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/equal-q.html).  `==` for [`strict-equal?`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/strict-equal-q.html).

NB. Spaces are important because `1=1` would be recognised as a word (and an invalid word at that).

#### 4

```
why?
```

Explains the last error (that occurred) in more detail. It does this by opening your web-browser on the necessary webpage that documents the error.

For eg. `foobar` would produce the error `** Script error: foobar has no value`.  Typing
`why?` next will open browser window pointing at http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/errors/script-no-value.html

NB.  This is the first function call example given. `why?` is a word which points to a defined function (`source why?` for details). When Rebol interpreter hits a word like this it invokes the function.  If the function requires any arguments then Rebol evaluates the necessary words that follow and passes them to the function.

#### 3

```
red
```

This returns a [`tuple`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/tuple.html) which in this case is a tuple of RGB values (for the colour red!).

NB. And `red` is not the only colour defined in Rebol - http://rebol2.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/color-names.html

BTW. Red also happens to be the name for an alternative version of Rebol - http://www.red-lang.org/

#### 2

```
no
```

Rebol comes with a few synonyms for `true` and `false`... `yes no on off`

NB. These are all just words in the Rebol lexicon (including `true` & `false`) so all can be redefined.  So if you peek underneath you'll find the truth is actually `#[true]` (literally!).

#### 1

```
;
```

Everything after a semicolon to end of the line is ignored by the Rebol interpreter.

NB. Space(s) are important to Rebol because it interprets the *words* it sees.   But `;` is one of those exceptions where it cuts across this.

#### Factoid

[Rebol](http://www.rebol.com/) is a dynamic programming language designed by [Carl Sassenrath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Sassenrath) with data exchange in mind.  NB. Douglas Crockford has cited Rebol for being an influence on JSON design.

It had been proprietary but Rebol 3 was finally [opensourced](https://github.com/rebol/rebol) on 12-12-2012 just before the world ended :) (according to the Mayan calendar!)

Comment: I'm sad this language isn't indev :c

Comment: @tac - Good news... it is "indev" :)   See Ren/C which is a community fork of Rebol.   In time this (or bits of it) will be fed back into mainline Rebol - https://github.com/metaeducation/ren-c

Answer (score 25):

## Smalltalk

[Smalltalk](https://smalltalkrenaissance.wordpress.com/) has five keywords. The entire spec fits on a single sheet of paper.

Smalltalk is a small language ;-), with only a minimum number of builtin semantic features - basically the language only defines the syntax for how messages are sent to objects (that's what others would name "virtual function calling").

However, it comes with a big class library. This is open for inspection and extension, and includes everything from numeric operations to UI frameworks to compilers, editors, debuggers and class browsers.

Smalltalk is pure object oriented, with no exceptions. Everything down to integers, characters, stack frames, methods and closures is represented as an instance of a class. This includes classes themself, which are instances of a metaclass.

Every class can be extended, modified, subclassed or reinherited at execution time.

Every Smalltalk dialect comes with a powerful IDE, which makes heavy use of the above dynamic possibilities. For example, it is possible to change code in the debugger and proceed execution without any limitation. Programs are developed inside the IDE - that means that your application classes and objects live in the same world. There is no required separation between the IDE objects and the application objects, and each can make use of the other. of course, you can also extent the IDE itself, while you are living in it.

For programmers, the combination of powerful IDE and high dynamics due to the very late binding, make this a great environment for rapid development.

## Length 1

Numbers evaluate to themselves - numbers are objects:

```
1
```

## Length 2

Character literals (constants) are preceeded by dollar signs:

```
$1
```

## Length 3

Strings are in single quotes, like in SQL:

```
'1'
```

## Length 4

Literal arrays are stored in hash & parenthesis.  These are created when a method is compiled, not at runtime, so it can improve performance:

```
#(1)
```

## Length 5

Mixed mode arithmetic is done transparently. Values are coerced automatically as required:

```
1+2.0
```

## Length 6

Blocks are anonymous functions. They can access the variables in their static scope. Blocks can outlive the dynamic scope in which they were created (i.e. they are Closures). Here is a simple block which returns its argument:

```
[:a|a]
```

## Length 7

Smalltalk has builtin support for Fractional numbers. These compute exact values and thus avoid the usual floating-point rounding errors. Multiplying 1/3 by 9 gives an exact integer 3, not 2.9999999 as in some other languages:

```
(1/3)*9
```

## Length 8

Scaled Decimal (FixedPoint) numbers are perfect for monetary values. They will print out with the specified number of fractional digits. Technically, they are fractions with a power-of-10 denominator. The following is a fixedpoint constant which always prints itself with 2 digits after the decimal point:

```
105.12s2
```

## Length 9

In Smalltalk, assignment is done with ":=". The "Value comparison" operator is "=", as opposed to the "Identity comparison", which is "==". The following will assign a boolean true or false to b, depending on the numerical value of x (i.e. works for x being of ANY numeric type, such as Float, Int, FixedPoint etc.)

```
b:=(x=10)
```

## Length 10

Intervals are collections, and as such can be used whereever other indexable collections can be used. For example, they can be enumerated with the "do:" messsage, passing a block like shown above; i.e. "(1 to:10) do:[:x |...]". The following creates an Interval representing the integer numbers from 1 to 10.

```
(1 to:10)
```

## Length 11

In Smalltalk, statements are separated by a period - just like in English. I added a space, to get 11 characters:

```
a:=0. b:=1.
```

## Length 12

There's no real syntax for method definitions. You can create methods dynamically, but that takes a lot more chars to demonstrate. This is what you could see as a method definition in a class browser:

```
+ s
^self, s
```

This is a binary method called "+", that takes an argument "s". And it returns (^) the concatenation of the receiver with the argument.
Define it in class String to instantly uglify the language!

## Length 13

This used to be `100 factorial`, but that impresses nobody...

```
999 factorial
```

Open a browser, type it in and `print it` (alt p in Squeak/Pharo), don't be scared. I wonder if it's right though? Probably is...

Just to be sure:

```
999 factorial / 998 factorial
```

> Squeak says it's 999

Comment: Please add a factoid that tells something about the language.

Comment: The entire Smalltalk language spec fits on a single sheet of paper (5 keywords).

Comment: Are you going to add snippets now?

Comment: Also, about length 11, in Smalltalk period _separates_ sentences. In English period _ends_ them. It's a bit of pedantry, but it's the same difference between C and Pascal, for instance (where it's more relevant)

Answer (score 25):

## Julia

**Factoid:** The [Julia language](http://julialang.org) was created as a fresh approach to technical and high-performance computing. It's free and open source.

**Note:** Though not a requirement of the competition, every snippet here can be evaluated at the Julia REPL without issue.

---

**Length 7:**

```julia
@time 1
```

Julia has built-in tools for profiling code. Among them are `@time` and `@allocated`, which are actually [macros](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/#macros). Here we're using the former.

From the documentation:

> A macro to execute an expression, printing the time it took to execute and the total number of bytes its execution caused to be allocated, before returning the value of the expression.

From the source code (at the time of writing):

```julia
macro time(ex)
    quote
        local b0 = gc_bytes()
        local t0 = time_ns()
        local g0 = gc_time_ns()
        local n0 = gc_num_pause()
        local nfs0 = gc_num_full_sweep()
        local val = $(esc(ex))
        local nfs1 = gc_num_full_sweep()
        local n1 = gc_num_pause()
        local g1 = gc_time_ns()
        local t1 = time_ns()
        local b1 = gc_bytes()
        time_print(t1-t0, b1-b0, g1-g0, n1-n0, nfs1-nfs0)
        val
    end
end
```

So what happens when we time the integer 1 at a freshly opened REPL?

```julia
julia> @time 1
elapsed time: 0.000521626 seconds (13880 bytes allocated)
1
```

13880 bytes allocated to print the number 1?! That seems a little excessive. But as it turns out, most of the allocation is due to the fact that Julia is JIT compiled. (Thanks to Martin Büttner for correcting me on the reason!) But if we were to run this again in the same session, we'd get something a little different:

```julia
julia> @time 1
elapsed time: 3.04e-6 seconds (80 bytes allocated)
1
```

That's much better!

---

**Length 6:**

```julia
≠(1,0)
```

What is that blasphemous character?! Those of us used to programming in the realm of ASCII may be initially put off by the presence of non-ASCII characters in source code. But fear not! Julia has your back. You can use a [finite set of Unicode characters](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/unicode-input) for input.

The `≠` operator is equivalent to `!=`, i.e. "not equal to". You can write it like `≠(1, 0)` as in the snippet, or like `1 ≠ 0`. Since 1 is obviously not 0, this returns `true`.

---

**Length 5:**

```julia
read!
```

No, Julia isn't commanding you to get up from your computer and read a book. In fact, `read!` is a function. In Julia, functions which modify their arguments end in `!`. In this case, `read!(s, a)` reads binary data from an input stream `s` and writes it to an array `a`.

---

**Length 4:**

```julia
1//0
```

Have you ever thought to yourself, "Man, I wish I could store an *exact* ratio of integers rather than a decimal value"? If so, you're in luck: Julia has a rational number type!

"But wait," you say, "I thought only Chuck Norris could divide by 0." Actually, Julia can deal with infinite rationals such as this one. However, it can't do `0//0`... Only Chuck Norris can do that.

---

**Length 3:**

```julia
3\4
```

Julia has a built-in function akin to Matlab's backslash (`\`) operator that performs matrix division using a polyalgorithm. So `A\b` solves the matrix equation `Ax=b` for `x`. When you give it integers, like in this example, it's solving the trivial equation `3x=4`, so the result is 4/3 = 1.333333.

---

**Length 2:**

```julia
im
```

This is a global constant which represents the "imaginary" number i, which is the principal square root of -1. Julia has a predefined type for complex numbers which supports all standard mathematical operations!

---

**Length 1:**

```julia
:
```

This returns `colon()`. The colon is used to construct ranges, like `start:stop` (assuming a step size of 1) or `start:step:stop`. Indeed, `:` actually calls the `colon()` function, so `1:4` is equivalent to `colon(1, 4)`.

Answer (score 24):

## Ceylon

**Factoid**

The Ceylon name is a play on the Java name (since it is a JVM language, and like many others, it secretly hope to be a better Java). Java and Ceylon (now Sri Lanka) are both islands in the Indian Ocean, one growing mostly coffee, the other growing mostly tea...

**Length 1**

```
;
```

Semi-colons are mandatory in Ceylon, unlike several modern languages. As said in the [language FAQ](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.1/faq/language-design/#semicolons_at_the_end_of_line), it is a compromise in syntax.
Note in that languages where semi-colons are optional (JavaScript, Scala, Lua, etc.) but where lines can be split arbitrarily, there are often cases where missing semi-colons can result in ambiguous or unexpected expressions...

**Length 2**

```
4T
```

is a valid literal number in Ceylon. It reads "four tera" and its value is `4_000_000_000_000`. Ceylon supports, like Java, digit grouping, and unlike lot of languages, number suffixes from `f` (femto, `e-15`) to `P` (peta, `e+15`).

**Length 3**

```
A|B
```

is a type which is the union of two disjoint types. This means that the value with this type can be of either `A` or `B` type. Since Ceylon does not support method overloading, it allows to define methods accepting various inputs in the same parameter, or various outputs. This feature is great to indicate a value can be null (it can't by default) and to support JavaScript dynamic types.

**Length 4**

```
{C*}
```

Type annotation for a stream of instances of the class `C`. This stream can be evaluated lazily. That's actually a shortcut for the `Iterable<C>` type.

**Length 5**

```
value
```

Ceylon is strictly typed, but is able of type inference, ie. you don't have to specify the type of a local variable (or of the return value of a local function) if the compiler can infer it.
You *have* to spell it out for class fields, function parameters, etc.
So you can declare a local variable with the `value` keyword in place of the real type, the compiler will guess its type from its assignment. Note that the term "variable" isn't right here, as it will be immutable (the default of local declarations, you have to declare them variable explicitly to mutate them).
I will continue to use the term variable here, even if they are immutable...

**Length 6**

```
Float?
```

Type of a float variable that might be null. By default, Ceylon values cannot be null. We have to declare explicitly if null is possible in the type of the declaration itself. And then, the Ceylon compiler forces us to check if the value is null. Thus, we can never have a `NullPointerException`, which doesn't exists in the language! It is one of the rare totally null-safe languages (Rust is another one, with a very different approach).
Note that this type declaration is actually a shortcut for `Float|Null`, ie. as seen above, the union of `Float` and of the `Null` type (which has only one instance: `null`).
Also note that `Float` is a class on its own, with methods. It is optimized to the Java `float` primitive by the compiler, though.

**Length 7**

```
Float[]
```

Type of a sequence of float values which can be empty. It is a shortcut for `Sequential<Float>` and can be written `[Float*]`, similar to the stream / iterable annotation. The difference is that a sequential can be indexed with the `[i]` notation, like an array. For the record, a `Sequence<T>` (or `[T+]`) is a sequential that cannot be empty. An empty sequential has the type `Empty` and is noted `[]`, of course.
Note that `seq[i]` where `seq` is a `Float[]` is of type `Float?` ie. the result can be `null`, if the index is out of the bounds.

**Length 8**

```
a else b
```

As seen above, if `a` is of type `A?` ie. can be `null`, you cannot use it without checking if it is null. It cannot be done with `a == null`, Ceylon offers various ways to check this. The code above is one of them: if `a` isn't null, use its value, otherwise, use the value of `b` (which cannot be null, of course; we can chain the checks...).

**Length 9**

```
\{BULLET}
```

is a valid Ceylon character: you can put any Unicode name between the braces, like `\{CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)}` or `\{WOMAN WITH BUNNY EARS}`.

**Length 10**

```
if(is T v)
```

As we seen, we can define union types, meaning that a variable can have one of several types, eg. `Integer` or `Float` (or `Byte` or... etc.).
If all the subtypes derivate from the same interface, we can use the methods of the parent interface.
For example, if we have `ArrayList<String> | LinkedList<String> dualList`, we can use `dualList.size` directly.
To use a method specific to one of the member of the union, you have to be sure it is of the given type.
For this, Ceylon offers a mechanism allowing in the same shot to check the type, and to downcast it to the specific type: `if (is ArrayList dualList) { Integer capacity = dualList.capacity; }` is legal because at this point, the compiler is sure to have an `ArrayList`.
It is equivalent to Java's `instanceof` and cast in the same shot, just safer: in Java, you can cast to something else than the type you checked!
Note that `is` is also an operator (resulting in a `Boolean`) that doesn't narrow down the type. `Boolean b = v is T;`

**Length 11**

```
"N ``p.n``"
```

Ceylon has string interpolation: you can embed in a literal string an expression between a pair of double backticks. The value of the expression will replace this placeholder. You can have simple local values, field access as shown, complex expressions or function calls. You can have literal strings (with interpolation too!) inside these expressions.

**Length 12**

```
f=(A p)=>-p;
```

Assigns to the `f` variable an anonymous function defined with the short syntax (fat arrow).
Functions are first-class citizens in Ceylon, they are just objects that can be assigned, passed as parameter, returned from another function, etc.
To fit in the length, I omitted the declaration of `f` which can be done earlier, for example: `A(A) f;`
Here, `f` returns the negation of the `p` parameter which has the type `A`.
Notice the usage of the negation operator `-` which must have been overloaded in the definition of `A`, which then must satisfy the interface `Invertible<A>`.
Ceylon doesn't support to define arbitrary operators (unlike Scala, where users can get crazy with this feature... :-)), nor even "true" operator overloading, but it supports operator polymorphism: operators are defined (by name, eg. `negated` for the unary minus) in specific interfaces (here `Invertible`) that classes needing these operators must implement (must satisfy, in Ceylon vocabulary).

**Length 13**

```
C<out T>(T t)
```

Declaration-site variance: the class `C` (the `class` keyword and the class body have been omitted for brevity) declares, in its definition, its type parameter `T` to be *covariant*, so `C<Car>` is a subtype of `C<Vehicle>` if `Car` is a subtype of `Vehicle`.
Collection interfaces (immutable by default), like `List` or `Set` are declared covariants.
Mutable collections must satisfy an additional interface with a *contravariant* declaration (`<out T>`), defining methods accepting the given class or any supertype of it: a mutable list of `Vehicle` must accept adding `Car`s.
Java is using use-site variance, like `List<? extends Car>`, defined on each `List` declaration. It is a bit more flexible but puts the burden on the users of the class, so is more cumbersome.
Since version 1.1, Ceylon also support use-site variance for Java interoperability reasons, but promotes declaration-site variance as the preferred method.
Also note the parameter list of the class: it defines both the parameters of the constructor of the class, and the corresponding fields, in the same shot! No need for these cumbersome `this.t = t;`...

**Length 14**

```
for(n in 0..5)
```

Ceylon doesn't have the classical C-like numerical `for` loop. Instead, it supports range definitions, and allows to iterate on them.
Here, `n` (whose type, `Integer`, is inferred) will go from 0 to 5, included. We could have written `0:6` instead (start, number of items). A range like `5..0` allows count-downs.
These notations are just syntax sugar for declaring instances of the `Range<T>` class. We can have ranges of numbers, characters or any other type `T` satisfying the `Enumerable` interface.

**Length 15**

```
return["",0.0];
```

Return statement in a function. Here, the type of the return value is `[ String, Float ]`. That's a tuple, of type `Tuple`.
A tuple is linked list (therefore a `Sequence`) which captures the static type of each individual element in the list.
We can then access safely each element by its index: `Float v = tuple[1];`; the compiler knows the size of the tuple and the type of each entry.
Tuples are a practical / compact mean to return several values from a function, where in Java we must create a *Pojo* (simple, often internal, class with just fields) for this.
Side note: Ceylon doesn't accept abbreviated, unreadable (IMHO) shortcuts for floats: neither `0.` nor `.0` are accepted, we must write `0.0`.

**Length 16**

```
shared T v=T(1);
```

A variable or attribute of a class (field in Java vocabulary) declaration. The variable is immutable (the default) and has a visibility annotation. Unlike Java fields, attributes (and variables) don't have an implicit default value  so they must be assigned at the declaration site (or must be, for attributes, in the parameter list of the class).
Note that `T(1)` creates a new instance of T with one parameter. Unlike Java, we don't need the `new` keyword.
`shared` is an annotation, not a keyword. Declarations are private by default, visible only in the code unit where they are declared: the class they belong to, or the package of the file where they are declared, if they are top-level.
`shared` extends the visibility to the parent: a shared declaration in a class is visible in the class enclosing this class, if any, or otherwise in the whole package containing the class. If a top-level declaration is shared, it is visible to everything that can see the containing package. If the package is shared, it is visible (and its shared declarations) by other packages in the same module, and by code in other modules which import that module.
Works like Russian puppets...
We introduced two concepts: packages are like in Java, folders in a folder hierarchy where the path defines a namespace / visibility unit. They allow to organize code in logical groups. Unlike Java, we *must* declare packages in a special file named `package.ceylon` in the package they belong to. That's where we declare if a package is shared (or not, by default). On the other hand, we don't have to declare the package on each file of the folder...
Modules are groups of packages, also declared in their own file (`module.ceylon`) at the root of the package hierarchy.
They *must* declare a version number, and *must* import the modules (with their version number) used in code belonging to this module. This allows modularity of the code with fine grained management of the required versions.

**Length 17**

```
assert(exists x);
```

Like in Java, `assert` throws an exception if its expression is false. But unlike Java, the compiler knows that after the `assert` statement, the condition is true. Here, the expression checks if `x`, of type `T?` (remember: that's `T | Null` ie. either `T` or `Null`), exists, ie. is not `null`. So the compiler accepts to use `x.foo` after the `assert` in the same block, because it known it isn't null.
`exists` can be used in a `if` too, if that's unsure. `assert` is used if the programmer knows for sure (except programming error!) that a variable initially null has been set to a non-null value at this point in the code. So `assert` is used here as a helper of the type checker of the compiler which hasn't flow analysis...

**Length 18**

```
class C(Float f){}
```

Declares a class and its constructor and its attributes in the same shot: the class' parameters are those of the constructor of the class, which then doesn't need to be defined explicitly. These parameters become attributes (equivalent to Java's fields), so no need for `this.f = f`, the syntax is streamlined, without boilerplate.
Note that a class can have only one constructor, because Ceylon doesn't support method overloading. Instead, it has parameters with default values (and therefore optional parameters), named parameters, etc.
It also implies that the class has an *initializer* section, containing a mix of declarations, statements and control structures. The initializer is executed every time the class is instantiated and initializes the state of the new instance of the class.

Comment: I used (and will use) some of Lucas Werkmeister's suggestions in my entry.

Comment: Semicolons aren't really optional in JavaScript. Either: you include them and your program does what you want, or you omit them and your program does probably something unexpected. In Scala and Lua, there is no time when semicolons are needed (save Scala C-style for loops); you may use them to group statements on to one line for golf.

Comment: @cat Lot of people code JavaScript without semi-colons. They just take care of avoiding these cases where they are necessary.
In Scala and Lua, you can find similar cases where semi-colons can be needed. AFAIK, in Scala, you can get out by inserting a blank line where the semi-colon is necessary.

Comment: Those people live dangerously. I also live dangerously, but when I do, I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. :P

Answer (score 24):

## Powershell

### Factoid:

As part of Microsoft's "Common Engineering Criteria" Powershell is designed to provide an automation platform and unify the management experience across all MS Server products. It leverages both the command line strength of a robust shell and the object awareness of the .NET infrastructure.

To handle a highly complex environments the standard naming convention for Powershell commands and functions follow a Verb-Noun structure (ex. `Get-Help`). This means that in favor of clarity and readability long names are actually encouraged. However because this is a "working admin's shell" there are 2 tools that keep this from being a burden. The first is "tab completion" for commands, parameters, filenames, etc. The second is a robust alias structure, many of these examples will feature aliases.

### Length 1

```
|
```

**Pipe** Piping is a common feature in Shells. Powershell improves on this by piping objects instead of strings.
So if (for example) a command selecting a file is on the left side of the pipe, then all of the complex attributes {Full path, directory, CreationTime, etc.} of that file are available on the right side of the pipe.

### Length 2

```
gm
```

**gm** is an alias for `Get-Member` which presents the various properties and methods that are available for an object. The most common of usage will be following a pipe.
Using `gm` on a file reveals 24 methods and 21 properties native to the `System.IO.FileInfo` object type.
`gm` is one of "the 3 things that reveal everything in Powershell" if you know only these 3 things you can use them to discover every function available.

### Length 3

```
gci
```

**gci** alias for `Get-ChildItem` (other aliases are `dir` and `ls`). In it's simplest sense `gci` retrieves the contents of a directory; you can apply filters, selectively recurse, and do everything that the DOS and Bash equivalents can.
The real power though is that Get-ChildItem has the ability to navigate ["Powershell Providers."](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847791.aspx) Providers exist for Environment Variables, the Registry, Certificates, and VM datastores; meaning that once you connect to the provider you can browse and interact with these abstract environments using familiar command-line navigation and logic.

### Length 4

```
help
```

**help** alias for `Get-Help`, and the second of "the three things that reveal everything". 
Help reveals structure, syntax, and function. For "professional" cmdlets and modules examples will be included. However help is dynamically aware of what's going on, so even for the most slapped together amateur functions you can use `get-help` to see the basic parameters and syntax.

### Length 5

```
h |fl
```

This is the first example that is not just a component but is actually full, complete, and practical in daily usage without any further parameters or modifications.

**h** alias for `Get-History`. Session History automatically logs your commands, and you can bring up recent commands with the up arrow. However to get a complete picture of command history use Get-History to present this array of information.

**|** pipe, in this case we are piping an array of HistoryInfo objects. (note: space before or after a pipe is optional... but it sure makes examples more readable. So this could also be a length 4 example. Working from the command line I tend to insert a space before as an old habit.)

**fl** is an alias for `Format-List`. Commands beginning with `Format-` are display options, no data is manipulated. Format-List accepts the piped input and displays the properties (for each array item) as a separate line.
This helps to quickly expose statistics like `ExecutionStatus`, `StartExecutionTime`, and `EndExecutionTime` for each history item.

### Length 6

```
(h)[0]
```

This is a very simple demonstration of some complex concepts.

**h** as we've already covered is an alias for the `Get-History` Cmdlet. This Cmdlet returns an array of objects.

**( )** brackets in an expression like this work like in a math formulas, you process what's inside the brackets to get the result before other operations are performed. So by using `(h)` or `(get-history)` we are designating that things outside the brackets will not be interacting with the command itself, but with the resulting array.

**[0]** this shows a way of directly specifying one element within an array, following standard comp-sci usage 0 represents the "first" element in that array. This example returns element 0 of the array returned by (Get-History). This can be useful when you want to systematically retrieve the Nth element of a sorted array, change the Nth letter of a string, or change the Nth octet of an IP address.

### Length 7

```
-Whatif
```

**-Whatif** is a "common parameter" enabling a safety routine within Powershell. Get-Help states: "When a cmdlet supports WhatIf, the cmdlet reports the expected effect of the command, instead of executing the command."

So if you have generated a list of files stored in the variable `$deletePending` and your next step is to run `$deletePending | Remove-item` if you want to make sure that a typo isn't going to ruin your week you can run a simulation of that command `$deletePending | Remove-item -whatif`  Each simulated step will output a line similar to:

```
What if: Performing operation "Remove file" on Target "C:\folder\file.tmp".
```

You can also turn WhatIf on for an entire session if you want to do extensive testing.
Most native "danger zone" cmdlets support the WhatIf parameter, and support can be integrated into your custom functions.

### Length 8

```
if(h){h}
```

This demonstrates the logical flow "IF the statement inside the brackets resolves to a Binary True, then run the statement in the curly brackets." It's important to understand that a Binary True ($true) can be achieved in multiple ways. Some examples:

```
if ($True)        if (1 -eq 1)        if (Get-Date)       if ("False")
```

That last one surprises people sometimes; but it's strong logic, "False" is a valid string and no valid string will ever equal Boolean False ($false).

In the 8 Length demo, the test being evaluated is "does (Get-History) return $False?"

`if ( h ) { h }` *will return $false if you run it in a brand new session*, run it a second time and it will return $true because now a history item exists. Being able to evaluate using cmdlets and functions can be very powerful, as long as you understand if and when a $false can be returned.

### Length 9

```
-computer
```

This parameter exists for cmdlets that support "implicit remoting" (such as get-process, stop-process, get-service, get-eventlog ). Generally speaking if you could do it through the management GUI or some form of WMI request you can now automate it through Powershell Cmdlets.

### Length 10

```
get-acl c:
```

If you have a file sharing structure then 1 of 2 things is true; either you need to "clean up the permissions one of these days" OR you've automated your standards.

In both cases `get-acl` and `set-acl` are better than the tools you've had before.

This is another tool that leverages powershell providers so it's just as easy to work with the ACL of `HKLM:\Sofware\ExampleSoft` as it is with `C:\Program Files\ExampleSoft`. Build a few scripts around the custom installs in your environment and you'll never grant "Local Admin" to a user again.

### Length 11

```
Get-Content
```

"Gets the content of the item at the location specified by the path, such as the text in a file. It reads the content one line at a time and returns a collection of objects , each of which represents a line of content."

Any good shell better be able to read a file's contents, so why is Get-Content worth mentioning?

```
-encoding  -raw  -stream  -delimiter  -readcount  -totalcount  -tail
```

Examining the parameters we see it can do a lot more than just push stdin to stdout.
For example we can pull the elusive Zone ID from the alternate data stream to see whether $file is flagged as originating from a trusted or untrusted zone.

```
Get-content -path $file -Stream Zone.Identifier
```

### Length 12 - modular function component 1

```
function f{}
```

Creates a function named f. Code within the curly brackets will be run whenever f is called.

In case you're wondering, since this is an empty function evaluations of f will find it equals $false.

### Length 13 - modular function component 2   (updated)

{my original length 13 was actually 12, so I'm re-working this entry}

```
$MyInvocation
```

This automatic variable exists for functions and other script blocks. It contains valuable diagnostic information about how a script block was invoked, including arguments and pipeline status.

If we simply place $myinvocation into our function, calls to f will return the invocation properties.

### Length 14 - modular function exploration1

```
$a=1..5+8
f @a
```

Running this will return the invocation properties from our function, which you can use to verify the breakdown I'm providing here.

This demonstrates populating a variable, and then calling our function with that variable as an argument. Since the ';' represents a break in the pipeline this can also be written as `$a=1..5+8;f @a`

`$a =` creates (or overwrites) the variable a

`1..5` populates $a with the numbers starting at 1 and ending at 5 (meaning that $a has actually become an array of integers).

`+8` looks like math, but since we're working with an array of integers this is really adding the integer 8 to the existing array

`f` since we defined 'f' as a function earlier we can now call it anywhere within the session just by using its name. Best Practice is to name functions following the Verb-Noun convention. Since function names are automagicly candidates for tab-completion do yourself a favor and only use short function names for silly things like code-golf.

`@a` Here the space separates the function name from it's arguments.

The @ (array identifier) is interesting. If we call `f $a` then we pass the array as a single argument.
By specifying `f @a` we pass each individual array element as an argument. The function will behave as if called like this `f 1 2 3 4 5 8`

### Length 15 - modular function component 3

```
$args| %{$_+$_}
```

If you ran the "Length 14" exploration code you'll see the "UnboundArguments" invocation property, the `$args` automatic variable contains an array of arguments passed to a function as undeclared parameters.

`%` is an alias of `Foreach-Object`, which accepts the piped object and individually submits each element to the following script block  `{  }`

`$_` contains the current object in the pipeline context.

`$_ + $_` since we are in a foreach context our current object is each individual integer in our array, we demonstrate that by adding each Integer to itself. Since the + operator is context aware it reacts appropriately to either integer or array contexts.

### Current Module:

```
Function f{
$myinvocation
$args| %{$_+$_}
}
```

Comment: now that you're at 12 you can show superfluous while loops! `h | % { $_ }`

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield  nah, all those spaces are optional :-) You mean h|%{$_} which is a 7 length. And I'll need 15 to do h|%{$_}|? -p id

Answer (score 24):

## [Go](http://golang.org/)

Go, also commonly referred to as golang, is a programming language initially developed at Google in 2007 by Robert Griesemer, Rob Pike, and Ken Thompson. It is a statically-typed language with syntax loosely derived from that of C, adding garbage collection, type safety, some dynamic-typing capabilities, additional built-in types such as variable-length arrays and key-value maps, and a large standard library.

[Link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/44804/edit) for myself, or anyone who wants to contribute to this answer.

**Length 14**

```
var x [9]int32
```

This is an example of how to create an fixed array. You can access it use normal indexing operation `x[8]` for example. You can iterate any array or slice using `for-range` statement, for example:

```
for index, value := range x { // value == x[index]
}
for index := range x {
}
for _, value := range x {
}
```

**Length 13**

```
var x []int32
```

This is a longer example of `slice`, slice is a struct that stores current length, capacity and pointer to an array. to get the capacity you can use `cap(x)`, to get the current length of the slice, you can use `len(x)` function. To add an element to the last element you can use `x = append(x,data)` function, if capacity equal to the current length, it will copied to another array, and the slice points to that new array.

**Length 12**

```
var x *int32
```

This is an example of pointer variable, a pointer most useful to change a value that declared outside function, for example:

```
func SquareIt(n *int32) {
  v := *n
  *n = v * v
}
```

This function would multiply a variable passed into it (you must prefix with `&` when passing non-pointer into pointers), for example:

```
y := int32(12)
SquareIt(&y)
fmt.Println(y) // 144
```

A pointer also can be used to change function owner's member, for example:

```
type Person struct {
   Age int
}
func (p Person) Aging1() { p.Age += 1 } // doesn't change the age
func (p *Person) Aging2() { p.Age += 1 } // change the age
func main() {
  me := Person{Age:28}
  me.Aging1() 
  fmt.Println(me.Age) // 28
  me.Aging2() 
  fmt.Println(me.Age) // 29
}
```

**Length 11**

```
interface{}
```

This is an example of a type that can hold anything. The `interface{}` translates to "any type that implements at minimum 0 function". Here's better use-case on how to use this keyword

```
type Stringer interface {
  String() string
}
```

That snippet above means that `Stringer` is a type that could hold anything that already implements `String() string` function (function named `String` that returns a `string`), for [example](http://play.golang.org/p/3Bi9YFPgJ6):

```
type Hooman struct {
  Name string
  Age int
}
func (h Hooman) String() string {
  return "I'm a hooman named " + h.Name + " " + strconv.Itoa(h.Age)
}
func main() {
  me := Hooman{}
  me.Name = "kis"
  me.Age = 28
  x := Stringer(me)
  fmt.Println(x.String()) // kis 28
}
```

**Length 10**

```
func X(){}
```

This is an example of how to create a function. This function named `X` that holds zero parameter and doesn't return anything. You can add parameters/arguments between the `()` and return type between the `){`, for example:

```
func Add(a int, b int) int {
  return a + b
}
```

Or alternative syntax:

```
func Add(a, b int) (c int) {
  c = a + b
  return
}
```

A function can have its own owner, this function often called method in another language, to set the ownership of a function, just type the owner between `func` and the function name, for example

```
type Person struct {
  Name string
  Age  int
}
func (p Person) Print() {
  fmt.Println("I'm a person named " + p.Name)
}
func main() {
  me := Person{"kis",28}
  me.Print()
}
```

**Length 9**

```
package X
```

This is an example of the first statement that you must type to create a package/library. The library would be called `X`, all function, type, constants or variables that declared capitalized, can be accessed from another package by typing `X.The_name_of_the_function_or_type_or_constants_or_variables` after including the package folder using `import` keyword. Normally the folder name is equal to the package name, visit [here](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) for more information about code organization.

**Length 8**

```
[]int{3}
```

This is an example on how to create a slice that points to an array that contains an element with value `3`. To increase the slice you may want to use `append` function, for example: `x := []int{3}; x = append(x,7)`, now that slice will point to an array that have a value of `3` and `7`, that equals to `[]int{3,7}`, to get the length of that slice, use `len` function, to get the capacity of underlying array, use `cap` function.

**Length 7**

```
strconv
```

This is the name of standard library that useful to convert mostly anything from/to a string, for example:

```
package main
import `strconv`
import `fmt`
func main() {
  fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(1234) + ` is a string now`)
}
```

**Length 6**

```
struct
```

Struct is a keyword to create a record or a new data structure, that compose another type, this is an example of how to create a new type called `Person`

```
type Person struct {
  Name string
  Age  int
}
```

**Length 5**

```
[]int
```

This is an example of `slice` data type, slice is a struct that have pointer to real array, a current length of the slice and capacity of that array. [Slice](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) is just like a microscope that shows only a part or whole of original array.

**Length 4**

```
x:=3
```

This is an example for a shortcut to create a variable named `x` and initialize it with `int` value of `3`. The longer version to do the same thing is: `var x int = 3`. There's no need to add semicolon at the end of each statement.

**Length 3**

```
1.2
```

This is an example on how to create a float constant with `float32` or `float64` depends on the context.

**Length 2**

```
``
```

Backquote is the `string` literal, inside those quote could be almost anything (including newline) except the backquote itself.

**Length 1**

```
1
```

This is the example of number literal, this number could be anything, `rune` (character), `uint8` or `byte`, `int8`, `uint16`, `int16`, `uint32`, `int32`, `uint`, `int`, `uint64` `int64`, `float32`, `float64` depends on the context, the default is `int`.

**Factoid**

[Gopher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gopher) (the mascot of go programming language) is a real animal (rodents family).

Answer (score 24):

## PostScript

#### Factoid

PostScript is a language designed for printer rasterization engines. It is nonetheless a mostly feature complete programming language based on stack manipulation. This makes it relatively easy to extend the drawing primitives.

PostScript can be executed by many devices, and programs. Aside GhostScript, if you include a encapsulation header, you can use programs such as Word, Illustrator, Indesign as preview (possibly live if you link the file) for your code. This means that surprisingly many users even on the Windows platform can execute your program with no extra installation.

#### One char snippet

```
2
```

Puts the number `2` topmost on your execution stack. Nothing fancy done with this yet, but hey, we have allocated some memory.

#### Two char snippet

```
==
```

Print and remove topmost item in stack to stdout. Since not all systems are guaranteed to have a meaningful stdout this may in fact do nothing. Raises an error if stack is empty.

#### Three char snippet

```
(a)
```

Push a string containing `a` to the stack.

#### Four char snippet

```
save
```

Save the state of your virtual machine and put a save object on top of your stack. You can then use `restore` on this object to return to the global saved state at any time.

#### Five char snippet

```
5 sin
```

Calculate the sine of 5 degrees. Postscript quite universally thinks of angles as degrees, as opposed to more mathematical radians of many languages use.

#### Six char snippet

```
moveto
```

When executing drawing instructions, PostScript acts like a plotter (or pen in hand). The `moveto` command  moves the virtual pen to a location specified by the two topmost items on the stack; topmost being the y direction and the second the x direction.

#### Seven char snippet

```
1 2 add
```

And finally we have enough chars to actually compute something trivial. Here we push `1` and `2` to the stack. Calling `add` then pops them both, adds them together, and pushes the sum onto the stack. Leaving `3` on top of the stack.

#### Eight char snippet

```
/v 9 def
```

Define symbol `v` as `9`. This is mostly equivalent to doing `v = 9` in most other languages. So now the previous example could look as `v 2 add` and it would result in 11 in the stack.

#### Ten char snippet

```
0 2 8{}for
```

A for-loop.  Normally you'd add spaces around the function `{}` but I'm running out of chars. This produces numbers even numbers 0 through 8, as the stepping is 2. So the stack after this would be `0 2 4 6 8`. 20 more chars and we can start drawing stuff. (not a good language for golfing)

#### Eleven char snippet

```
/a {add}def
```

Simple function definition; the function goes between the curly brackets and acts upon the stack. Note how it uses same mechanism as snippet 8. Now you could write the 7 char snippet as `1 2 a`.

#### Twelve char snippet

```
4 3 gt{1} if
```

So here you go some flow control, if 4 is greater than (`gt`) 3 execute function `{}` which in this case deposits 1 in the stack.

#### Thirteen char snippet

0 0 6 0 5 arc

Make a 5 degree arc with a radius of 6 at the origin (0, 0). Note this does not actually draw anything yet; it prepares for drawing by constructing something that's called a 'user path'.

#### Fourteen char snippet

```
20 0 translate
```

Changes the transformation matrix so that your drawings are henceforth positioned 20 units more right. This is useful if you want to repeat the same drawing routine in different places. PostScript coordinates are measured from the bottom left corner of your drawing surface and each unit is one PostScript Point (a unit Adobe invented) that is 1/72 of an inch.

#### Eighteen char snippet

```
1 1 5 5 rectstroke
```

Draws a stroked rectangle onto the canvas in the lower left corner of your page.

#### Twenty-one char snippet

```
4 4 moveto 2 5 lineto
```

Puts a line segment into the drawing buffer.

Comment: @mbomb007 Edit appreciated

Comment: Need one more number for `x y radius ang0 ang1 arc -`. I only noticed this because I've [implemented `arc`](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.postscript/YiuM6lj5ngY/4Lo9AW0M2xgJ).

Comment: When you get to 19, you can `0 0 1 1 rectstroke`.

Comment: @luserdroog right you are will fix as soon as i have a computer in front of me.

Answer (score 24):

## QBasic

The programming language that everybody grew up on<sup>[citation needed]</sup>--at least, everyone who grew up with MS-DOS during the 90s.

#### Factoid

QBasic is actually an interpreter and an IDE together.  When you enter code, the QBasic editor automatically formats it for things like whitespace and capitalization.  The [QB64 emulator](http://qb64.net), which I'm using to test my programs, gives the option of turning auto-formatting off, allowing a few nice golfing shortcuts in an otherwise fairly verbose language.

#### Length 1

```
1
```

This is a valid QBasic program--but only because QBasic allows line numbers.  The above is therefore an empty statement (on line number 1), which does nothing.

#### Length 2

```
?a
```

Lots of stuff going on here:

- `?` is a shortcut for `PRINT`.
- `a` is a variable. Since it doesn't have a type suffix and hasn't been declared with `DIM`, it is numeric; so it is auto-initialized to `0`.
- Thus, this program is basically equivalent to `PRINT 0`. But because QBasic is optimized (?) for outputting numeric data in tables, what it actually prints is  `0` . (The leading space is so `1` and `-1` will line up properly, and I suspect the trailing space is so that printing multiple numbers in a row won't result in something like `-1-2-3`.)

#### Length 3

```
CLS
```

QBasic doesn't use an output stream like C-based languages; instead, it uses a cursor to write stuff to a window (see snippet 13 for more on that). The DOS implementation doesn't clear the window between runs, so it can start to get cluttered after a while:

```
 0 
 0 
 0
```

--which is why most QBasic programs have the CLear Screen command somewhere near the beginning.

(The QB64 emulator starts over with a blank screen each time you run your program, which I find just a little disappointing.)

#### Length 4

```
BEEP
```

Does [just what you think it does](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9004/play-a-sound-any-sound/11560#11560).

What I like about QBasic is that it has fun commands like this *built into the syntax*, whereas other languages usually require external libraries or weird workarounds. In Python, for example, the quickest way to get a beep is the extremely cryptic `print("\a")`; but that doesn't even work in all environments (in particular, the IDLE shell that comes with Python prints a bullet character instead).

#### Length 5

```
?2^42
```

`^` is exponentiation, of course. (Don't know what possessed C and its derivatives to use it for bitwise xor.)

Despite the fact that this looks like integer math, we don't get an overflow. The default numeric type in QBasic is actually `SINGLE`, which is a floating-point number that shows (up to) seven significant digits. If the fractional part is zero, it will display as an integer: for example, `PRINT 1.0` outputs `1`. The result above has more than seven significant digits, however; so we get it in scientific notation as `4.398047E+12`.

Annotating one of the operands with the `#` suffix would coerce the expression to `DOUBLE` precision, giving up to fifteen significant digits: `?2#^42` gives `4398046511104`.

#### Length 6

```
?1:RUN
```

Our first multi-statement program! `:` is a statement separator.

The `RUN` command can be used in a few different ways. If you give it the name of another QBasic source file, it will switch execution to that program. If you give it a line number in the current program, it will restart the program at that line. (This is different from a `GOTO` because all variables are cleared, as if starting the program from scratch.) And if you don't specify an argument, it will restart the program from the top. The code above prints `1` infinitely.

If you don't want the `1`s on their own lines, you could use `?1;:RUN`--the semicolon suppresses the newline when printing. But that will actually give you  `1  1  1 ...` (see the length-2 snippet for why). To fill the screen with `1`s, you'd need to use a string: `?"1";:RUN`.

#### Length 7

```
INPUT x
```

The `INPUT` statement by default displays a `?` prompt and waits for the user to enter a value. Lacking a type suffix, `x` is a single-precision numeric variable, so anything like `3.14` or `-42` is valid input. What happens if you try to enter something that's not a number?

```
? Jabberwocky
Redo from start
?
```

It's a bit cryptic, and it can royally mess up the alignment if your program is using some kind of [text-based user interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface), but at least the program doesn't [crash](http://ideone.com/KGsZTK), [interpret the input as 0](http://ideone.com/2p9dRT), or anything weird like that. ;^)

<sub>Note: QB64 doesn't even let you type invalid characters when an INPUT statement asks for a number.</sub>

#### Length 8

```
PLAY"CF"
```

Music is yet another feature awesomely built in to QBasic. This code plays two quarter notes (middle C and middle F). A `PLAY` string has ways of changing the octave, playing sharps and flats, changing the duration of notes, and so much more!

#### Length 9

```
SCREEN 12
```

Different `SCREEN` modes in QBasic allow for different graphical capabilities: various resolutions, color vs. black-and-white, text-only or graphics-capable. Historically, these were included to account for differences among display hardware. The default mode, `SCREEN 0`, is text-only, so any program with graphics in it has to start with a `SCREEN` statement. (Pretty pictures later if I get more votes!)

#### Length 10

```
?4*ATN(1#)
```

Would you care for some pi? QBasic has a good number of math functions built in, ArcTaNgent among them. The `#` type annotation is used here to make the resulting value `DOUBLE`, so we get more digits: `3.141592653589793`.

#### Length 11

```
COLOR 2:?42
```

Time to get colorful.

[image: Green 42] <sup>*(Shown 2x actual size)*</sup>

In the default `SCREEN 0`, QBasic offers 16 foreground colors:

[image: The 16 colors in QBasic]

Each color 8-15 is a lighter version of the corresponding 0-7 color. The darker colors 0-7 are also available as background colors, and adding 16 to a foreground color makes it blink! (See [this thread](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=33506), particularly the bottom post, for a great historical explanation.) So, since a `COLOR` statement affects everything subsequently printed, we can write this:

`COLOR 25,4`

and see this:

[image: Blinking "Press any key"]

Trippy.

#### Length 12

```
DRAW"F3U7R9"
```

The `DRAW` command takes a string of codes and draws stuff on the screen. As a graphics command, it cannot be used in the default screen mode, so you'll need to combine this snippet with snippet 9 in order to run it. This example goes 3 pixels diagonally down and right, 7 pixels up, and 9 pixels right, for a tiny square root symbol:

[image: QBasic DRAW command--square root symbol] <sup>*(Shown 2x actual size)*</sup>

#### Length 13

```
LOCATE 7,8:?9
```

Recall (from snippet 3) that QBasic outputs text to a window, not an output stream. The `LOCATE` command allows you to set the cursor location for output. So if you want to display something halfway down the screen, you don't need to print a bunch of newlines first--just `LOCATE` to the right row and column.

[image: Using LOCATE command]

Importantly, this doesn't affect any other text on the screen (except when directly overwriting it), which makes QBasic very straightforward for creating [textual user interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface)--or [dungeon games](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/49082/16766). Most languages would have to use control codes or a library like curses.

#### Length 14

```
GOTO a
?1
a:?2
```

What would QBasic be without `GOTO`? The much-maligned feature is alive and well here, allowing arbitrary jumps in program flow to defined labels. The above snippet, of course, skips to the third line and outputs `2`.

A label must come at the beginning of a line. It can be any identifier followed by a colon; or, it can be a BASIC-style line number, sans colon.

While it is true that 1) most uses of `GOTO` can be replaced by conditionals or looping constructs and 2) those that are too complicated for this treatment are probably a bad idea to begin with, I still like `GOTO`, for a couple of reasons. First, it's how assembly works under the hood, so learning it first in QBasic is valuable practice. Second, I still think it's more readable (and less redundant) to write code like this:

```
getNumber:
INPUT x
IF x = 0 THEN PRINT "Enter a nonzero number": GOTO getNumber
PRINT "The inverse is"; 1/x
```

than the Python equivalent:

```
x = float(input())
while x == 0:
    print("Enter a nonzero number")
    x = float(input())
print("The inverse is", 1/x)
```

#### Length 15

```
RANDOMIZE TIMER
```

QBasic does (pseudo)random numbers via the `RND` function, which is normally invoked without arguments and returns a random number in the range `[0, 1)`. However, you'll get the same sequence on each run of the program unless you seed the PRNG with the `RANDOMIZE` statement. The usual seed is `TIMER`, which returns the number of seconds since midnight. This provides a different seed on each run of the program... at least, if you don't run it at exactly the same time each day.

If you *do* want the same numbers each run (maybe for testing purposes), you can pass a constant to `RANDOMIZE`--or just put `RANDOMIZE` without specifying a seed, in which case you'll be prompted when you run your program:

```
Random-number seed (-32768 to 32767)?
```

Nobody can say QBasic isn't user-friendly.

#### Length 16

```
CIRCLE(9,9),8,,2
```

Graphics command: combine with snippet 9 to run.

QBasic's drawing commands are interesting because they each have a unique syntax, tailored to make the most sense for the particular command. The syntax for `CIRCLE` is `CIRCLE (x, y), radius[, options]`. (If you think that's odd, just wait till we get to see `LINE` in snippet 18.)

The first option to `CIRCLE` is `color`: we could have drawn a green circle with `CIRCLE(9,9),8,2`. But we've got an extra character to play with, so let's leave the color option blank (defaulting to white) and look at the next option. This happens to be `startRadian`. A value of `2` means that instead of a full circle, we get an arc of 2π - 2 radians:

[image: Arc of circle] <sup>*(Shown 2x actual size)*</sup>

(Note that this apparently follows the standard quadrants system, despite the fact that QBasic has the origin at the top left with the positive y-axis pointing down.) The remaining `CIRCLE` options are `endRadian` and `aspect`, which allows you to draw ellipses:

```
CIRCLE(51,26),50,,,,0.5
```

[image: Half-squashed circle]

#### Length 17

```
LINE INPUT s$:?s$
```

Reads an arbitrary line of text from the user and echoes it back.

What's important here is the word "arbitrary." The reason for the existence of `LINE INPUT` is that the regular `INPUT` command can't read commas. It treats them as field separators, so you can get two strings in one go by doing `INPUT a$, b$`. (Also useful for reading comma-separated data from a file.) But what if your input contains commas? Well, you can wrap it in double quotes and it'll treat the comma as part of the string. But what if your input also contains double quotes? That's when you need `LINE INPUT`, which simply reads everything until you hit enter.

#### Length 18

```
LINE(1,1)-(9,9),,B
```

Graphics command: combine with snippet 9 to run. Draws a line from `(1,1)` to `(9,9)`, right? Well... not exactly.

[image: It's a box!] <sup>*(Shown 2x actual size)*</sup>

This *would* create a diagonal line, except that we've also specified the `B` option for "box." So instead of a line, we get a rectangle. There's also `BF` for "box, filled." (As in snippet 16, the empty space between commas is for the unused color argument.)

I'm actually a fan of this unusual syntax, whenever it makes sense for the given command. I find that it's a mnemonic aid. Contrast the above with a function that takes a gajillion* positional arguments--you can never remember which one is which--or half a gajillion keyword arguments--you 1) have to remember the names of the keywords and 2) can end up with a pretty long line of code if you use multiple arguments. (I know the counterarguments; I'm just saying that this is something I enjoy about QBasic.)

<sup>* Slight hyperbole.</sup>

#### Length 19

```
?0:PAINT(10,4),9,15
```

Graphics command: combine with snippet 9 to run.

`PAINT` takes a starting point, a fill color, and a border color. It does a flood fill until it hits border-colored pixels or the edge of the screen. It's typically used to fill circles, rectangles, and other graphics figures. But hey, printed text is just pixels on the screen too:

[image: 0 donut filled with blue(berry) jelly] <sup>*(Shown 2x actual size)*</sup>

#### Length 20

```
?ASC(INPUT$(1));
RUN
```

`INPUT` and `LINE INPUT` aren't the only ways to get input in QBasic. The `INPUT$(n)` function reads *n* keypresses and returns them as a string. (It can also be used to read from a file or a serial port.) `INPUT$` does not display a prompt or echo the characters to the screen as they are typed. It therefore has a myriad of uses, from password entry to the famous "Press any key to continue."

The above program waits until the user presses a key, prints the ASCII code of that character, and loops infinitely using `RUN` (see snippet 6). Entering `ABC123<esc><cr><tab><bksp>` will result in output of

```
 65  66  67  49  50  51  27  13  9  8
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I gave you the 13th upvote, and I'm interested in seeing what you can do with 13 characters (you mentioned it in your length 3 snippet). I grew up on QB45 and absolutely loved it.

Answer (score 24):

## Scratch

<sub>**Oops!** I kind of feel like a terrible person for not updating this lately. I'll try to be more consistent with my updates, e.g. when somebody votes I'll update.. Forgive me? :)</sub>
<sub>**Oops!** Wow, did it again. A link or two was broken; that should be fixed now.</sub>

---

[Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu) is a graphical programming language created by MIT. Because it's graphical and block-based, rather than counting the number of characters, I'm going to count the number of blocks (after all, the number of characters could change with translations).

Rather than getting a screen shot of every single script I'll give you a link to a [Scratchblocks](http://scratchblocks.github.io) page. I'll also post the code for it below.

This answer is in development! ;)

Um, also, maybe read the scripts from bottom to top..? :P

---

### Length 11

- [Scratch Official Editor](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/83165784/#editor)
- [Scratchblocks](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#when%20[space%20v]%20key%20pressed%0Aset%20[Playing?%20v]%20to%20[1]%0Aset%20[Score%20v]%20to%20[0]%0Areset%20timer%0A%0Awhen%20this%20sprite%20clicked%0Aif%20%3C(Playing?)%20=%20[0]%3E%0A%20%20change%20[Score%20v]%20by%20[1]%0Aend%0A%0Awhen%20[timer%20v]%20%3E%20(10)%0Aset%20[Playing?%20v]%20to%20[0])

Code:

```
when [space v] key pressed
set [Playing? v] to [1]
set [Score v] to [0]
reset timer

when this sprite clicked
if <(Playing?) = [0]>
  change [Score v] by [1]
end

when [timer v] > (10)
set [Playing? v] to [0]
```

Well, we've got three whole scripts here! This should be simple enough to understand, but I'll explain it anyways.

```
when [space v] key pressed
set [Playing? v] to [1]
set [Score v] to [0]
reset timer
```

When the space key is pressed, we want to set the playing variable to 1 (e.g. true), the score variable to 0 (e.g. no points yet), and **reset the timer.** The timer is an important part of this project!

```
when this sprite clicked
if <(Playing?) = [0]>
  change [Score v] by [1]
end
```

When the sprite is clicked on, if we are currently playing, change the score by 1.

```
when [timer v] > (10)
set [Playing? v] to [0]
```

When the timer is greater than 10 (e.g. 10 seconds have elapsed since the timer has last been reset) set the playing variable to 0. Because it is now 0, in the when-sprite-clicked script the score is no longer increased.

By the way, here is the costume that the sprite uses:

[image: Sprite Costume]

> A key bit of information about this project is that you can have multiple scripts inside a single project. Each of these scripts will be called according to their hat block, so `when this sprite clicked` will happen when this sprite is clicked on!
>
> > Getting a bit technical here, but **Scratch does not use multiple threads.** Instead you should think of scripts being stuck into a list of things to do. It's a bit complicated but works similarly to the way JavaScript does.
> >
> > Also, keep in mind that many blocks will automatically update the screen (as well as control events, for example, a loop looping) and will tell Scratch's interpreter to go on to the next script occurring simultaneously. You can get around this by putting your script inside of a run-without-screen-refresh custom block as shown in length 8.

### Length 10

- [Scratch Official Editor](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/83167236/#editor)
- [Scratchblocks](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#when%20GF%20clicked%0Aset%20tempo%20to%20(pick%20random(30)%20to%20(120))%20bpm%0Aset%20[Note%20v]%20to%20[55]%0Arepeat%20(3)%0A%20%20play%20drum%20(15%20v)%20for%20(1)%20beats%0Aend%0Arepeat%20(10)%0A%20%20play%20note%20(Note)%20for%20(0.3)%20beats%0A%20%20change%20[Note%20v]%20by%20[1]%0Aend)

Code:

```
when GF clicked
set tempo to (pick random(30) to (120)) bpm
set [Note v] to [55]
repeat (3)
  play drum (15 v) for (1) beats
end
repeat (10)
  play note (Note) for (0.3) beats
  change [Note v] by [1]
end
```

This one hopefully won't blow your mind too much. It's a simple melody with a drumroll. I don't think it needs that much describing. ;)

#### [(Scratch Official Editor)](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/81740786/#editor) <sub>[(Scratchblocks)](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#//%20Sprite:%20Cat%0Awhen%20GF%20clicked%0Ago%20to%20x:%20(-130)%20y:%20(90)%0Apoint%20towards%20[Apple%20v]%0Arepeat%20until%20%3Ctouching%20[Apple%20v]%3E%0A%20%20move%20(2)%20steps%0Aend%0Abroadcast%20[got%20apple%20v]%0A%0A//%20Sprite:%20Apple%0Awhen%20I%20receive%20[got%20apple%20v]%0Ahide)</sub> Length 9 Snippet:

```
// Sprite: Cat
when GF clicked
go to x: (-130) y: (90)
point towards [Apple v]
repeat until <touching [Apple v]>
  move (2) steps
end
broadcast [got apple v]

// Sprite: Apple
when I receive [got apple v]
hide
```

What's so nice about Scratch is that it's scripts are *very* self-explanatory. I probably don't even need to explain to you what this does for you to figure it out (especially if you run the program by going to the above link).

However, this example does introduce a few new things I haven't shown yet:

- **Sprites:** These are Scratch's idea of *things* in the world (stage). A sprite is generally what you use when you want to add a character to your scene. Whenever you [open up the editor](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/editor/), you already get pre-loaded a sprite - it's that scratch cat! You can use as many sprites as you want in your program as well. Learn more about Sprites and how to create them on the [wiki](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Sprite).
- **Broadcasts:** A broadcast is as it sounds (literally) - it's a message that is sent through the project to every single sprite in the program. You use the **when I receive** hat to make something happen when a script is broadcasted. Broadcasts are a very important part of the programming language and you can learn more about them on the wiki [here](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Broadcast).

One last cool thing about this project is that if you change the numbers in the `go to x: y:` block it will always work - so why not try it?

#### [(Scratchblocks)](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#when%20GF%20clicked%0Ainsta%0A%0Adefine%20insta%0Apen%20down%0Arepeat%20(360)%0A%20%20turn%20cw%20(1)%20degrees%0A%20%20move%20(1)%20steps%0Aend%0Apen%20up) Length 8 snippet:

```
when GF clicked
insta

define insta
pen down
repeat (360)
  turn cw (1) degrees
  move (1) steps
end
pen up
```

Boom - custom procedures! I'd just like to clarify here - this is an instant custom block, or as [I](https://github.com/liam4) and [some](https://github.com/jmoenig) [friends](https://github.com/brianharvey) like to call them, atomic procedure. All that means is the block runs in a single frame - which is quite important for turtle graphics!

Here is a screenshot of the script, and the dialog I used to make the custom block:

[image: Atomic Functions]

#### [(Scratchblocks)](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#when%20GF%20clicked%0Aask%20[Hexadecimal%20decoder%20-%20please%20type%20a%20hex%20number%20WITHOUT%20THE%200x%20PART:]%20and%20wait%0Asay%20(join%20[]%20((join%20[0x]%20(answer))%20-%20(0)))) Length 7 snippet:

```
when GF clicked
ask [Hexadecimal decoder - please type a hex number WITHOUT THE 0x PART:] and wait
say (join [] ((join [0x] (answer)) - (0)))
```

Oh, hey! Scratch has hexadecimal decoding support! Who would have guessed?* Simply use `((join [0x] [###]) - (0))` to decode some hexadecimal.

#### [(Scratchblocks)](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#when%20GF%20clicked%0Aask%20[Hexadecimal%20decoder%20-%20please%20type%20a%20hex%20number%20WITHOUT%20THE%200x%20PART:]%20and%20wait%0Asay%20(join%20[Here%20is%20your%20number:%20]%20((join%20[0x]%20(answer))%20-%20(0)))) Length 6 snippet:

```
when GF clicked
set [var v] to [0]
repeat (10)
  change [var v] by (1)
  say (var) for (0.5) secs
end
```

[Variables](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Variable) in Scratch are represented by their own orange blocks - to declare one, you press the button **Make a variable** inside the Data category. This creates a new block, ***`name`***, in the Data category. To manipulate it, use the [variable blocks](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Variables_Blocks). All variables also have an (optional) [watcher](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Watcher) which can be customized - see the watcher's wiki article for more information!

#### [(Scratchblocks)](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#pen%20down%0Aclear%0Arepeat%20(180)%0A%20%20move%20(2)%20steps%0A%20%20turn%20cw%20(2)%20degrees%0Aend) Length 5 snippet:

```
pen down
clear
repeat (180)
  move (2) steps
  turn cw (2) degrees
end
```

Here we demonstrate - like all good programming languages should be able to - [turtle graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics)! Just because Scratch is a visual programming language really gives it just that extra bit of *fun* when you're programming, even more so with the pen!

#### [(Scratchblocks)](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#forever%0A%20%20play%20note%20((timer)%20mod%20(50))%20for%20(0.5)%20beats%0Aend) Length 4 snippet:

```
forever
  play note ((timer) mod (50)) for (0.5) beats
end
```

Scratch has many built in instruments - the simplest way to play a note is via the *`play note for beats`* block. Keep in mind the default [instrument](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Instrument) is 1 (piano) and the default [tempo](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Tempo_(value)) is 60bpm. Using blocks found in the [Sound Category](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Sound_Blocks) you can do things like [change the instrument](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Set_Instrument_to_()_(block)), [play](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Play_Sound_()_(block)) [sounds](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Play_Sound_()_Until_Done_(block)) you [import](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Import#Sounds_2), and even use the built in [drum set](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Play_Drum_()_for_()_Beats_(block))!

#### [(Scratchblocks)](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#when%20%5Bspace%20v%5D%20key%20pressed%0Apoint%20towards%20%5Bmouse-pointer%20v%5D%0Amove%20(10)%20steps) Length 3 snippet:

```
when [space v] key pressed
point towards [mouse-pointer v]
move (10) steps
```

When the space key is pressed, it moves the selected sprite toward the mouse. This makes it easier to demonstrate moving towards the mouse as you don't need to move the script whenever you want to change direction (and it would still only be able to go towards the east edge of the stage).

---

#### [(Scratchblocks)](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#point%20towards%20%5Bmouse-pointer%20v%5D%0Amove%20(10)%20steps) Length 2 snippet:

```
point towards [mouse-pointer v]
move (10) steps
```

When the script is clicked, it moves the sprite ten steps towards the mouse when clicked.

#### [(Scratchblocks)](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#move%20(10)%20steps) Length 1 snippet:

```
move (10) steps
```

When the script is clicked, it moves the sprite ten steps (pixels) in the direction it's facing, which, assuming you're using a non-touched-so-far sprite, will be towards the right (90° in Scratch).

---

Factoid: Scratch was originally released in 2007 (it was made in very early stages in 2003 or 2002 I believe) and now has over 7 million people using it (Scratchers) and over <s>10</s> **11** million projects created. It's used all around the world as well. Check out the [statistics](https://scratch.mit.edu/statistics/) page to see more stats about Scratch, and try it out online [here](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/editor/?tip_bar=getStarted). It's free!

<sup>* The [Advanced Topics](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/31/) would. :)</sup>

Comment: Added the second.

Comment: Added the third.

Comment: oops I suppose I should update this

Comment: Added the fourth, fifth, and sixth!

Comment: Also added to the language list on the first post.

Comment: Added the seventh, eighth, and ninth. Need to keep more of an eye on this.. forgive me? :)

Comment: Forgot to say I added the tenth and eleventh. Now I have to add the twelfth. o_o

Comment: Don't forget to add #12-17 :D

Comment: I'm working on it.. any ideas? :P

Comment: @towerofnix Prime numbers?

Comment: Nice conversation down here in the comments!

Answer (score 23):

### Dart

**Length 17:**

```
a.forEach(print);
```

Dart's first class functions offer concise coding patterns. Here, the `print` function is called for each element of `a`. This is the equivalent of the following:

```dart
a.forEach((e) => print(e));
```

**Length 16:**

```
a({b: 42}) => b;
```

Functions can have named parameters by using curly braces. Named parameters are optionally passed in by name by the caller, and can have a default value.

```dart
print(a());      // 42
print(a(b: 11)); // 11
```

**Length 15:**

```
int get x => 9;
```

You can define getters for a class that return a value. By default defined class fields create implicit getters and setters, but you can use the `get` and `set` keywords to define explicit custom getters and setters.

**Length 14:**

```
'''a$b

 c
''';
```

Multi-line Strings are created in Dart using triple quotes. String interpolation still works.

**Length 13:**

```
typedef C(a);
```

You can use the `typedef` keyword to assign a name to a function type. Here, `C` defines a function that takes a single argument. Now we can refer to `C` where we a need a function with that signature:

```dart
k(C c) => c;
```

And calling `k`:

```
k((a) => 4);
```

This is all very similar to the previous snippet, but can simplify things greatly if we need to continuously refer to a function type.

**Length 12:**

```
a(b()) => b;
```

Dart functions are first class. Here `a` is a function that takes another function as an argument and returns it. You could call `a` like this:

```dart
a(() => 4);
```

Note that the result of this is not 4, but rather a function with the signature `() => dynamic`.

**Length 11:**

```
int _a = 5;
```

Dart uses `_` as a privacy modifier. Fields and methods prepended with `_` can only be accessed in the library that they are part of.

**Length 10:**

```
A(this.x);
```

Dart has syntax sugar in place for constructors that simply set fields. When using `this.field` in a constructor, the field is automatically set to the passed in argument. The above concise code is equivalent to the following:

```dart
A(x) {
  this.x = x;
}
```

**Length 9:**

```
Z.blank()
```

Dart methods, including constructors, cannot be overloaded. If you want to have multiple constructors for a class, you can use named constructors instead. Using a named constructor is straightforward:

```dart
Z z = new Z.blank();
```

**Length 8:**

```
main(){}
```

The shortest Dart program you can write. Every Dart program requires a `main` function as an entry point.

**Length 7:**

```
a()=>4;
```

You can use fat arrows for short hand functions. The above code is equivalent to:

```dart
a() {
  return 4;
}
```

**Length 6:**

```
a as B
```

The `as` keyword allows you to cast an object to any type, in this case the variable `a` is cast to type `B`. This is very useful when you know the type of an object returned by a dynamic method and want the tooling to reflect that. For instance, if you were working with HTML and queried the DOM for an element, you could specify the type of the element, even though that type is not actually returned:

```dart
InputElement input = querySelector('#someInput') as InputElement;
// Go ahead and use input safely as an InputElement
```

**Length 5:**

```
'A$k'
```

`$` is used within Strings for interpolation. In this example if `k` was a variable with a value of `wkward`, the full value of the interpolated String would be `Awkward`.

**Length 4:**

```
true
```

Unlike other languages such as JavaScript, in Dart `true` is the only value that is `true`. The same applies to `false`. Values such as `0`, `1`, `''`, `null` are not truthy.

**Length 3:**

```
var
```

Var allows a variable to refer to any type of object. Tools will attempt to infer the actual type of the object.

**Length 2:**

```
{}
```

Dart supports map literals.

**Length 1:**

```
;
```

Semi-colons are mandatory to terminate a statement.

**Factoid:** Dart is an [optionally typed](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/optional-types/) language, which means you can add types to aid developers and tools, but they have no effect on your program's semantics - it will run the same whether you add types, or don't, or even add incorrect types.

Comment: Can `;`, `{}`, and `var` run as standalone statements without warnings or errors in Dart? I'm unfamiliar with the language.

Comment: They can't. It will take a quite a bit of characters to get to something that will run, since Dart requires at a minimum: `main(){}`.

Answer (score 23):

## [아희(Aheui)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Aheui)

아희(Aheui) is the first esoteric programming language which uses Hangul, the Korean alphabet. The word '아희' means '아이' in Old Korean, which means 'child'.

Aheui works similar to Befunge. It has 26 stacks and one queue.

---

### Factoid

There is a [Twitter bot](https://twitter.com/aheui/) which runs Aheui code for you.

[You can try programs below at here.](http://jinoh.3owl.com/aheui/jsaheui_en.html)

---

### Length 1

```
ㅎ
```

This is most simple program in Aheui. It does nothing and terminates.

#### Explanation

```
    Initial  Medial   Final  Explanation
----------------------------------------
ㅎ
    ㅎ                  Terminates program
```

---

### Length 2

```
아희
```

Yes, the name itself is also a valid, harmless program.

#### Explanation

```
    Initial  Medial   Final  Explanation
----------------------------------------
아
    ㅇ                       Initial ㅇ does nothing
             ㅏ                Move cursor by one character right
----------------------------------------
희
    ㅎ                       Terminates program
             ㅢ                (not executed)
```

---

### Length 3

```
밯망희
```

This is simple character code converter. Surprisingly, it is shorter than same C or Python program.

*Side note: '밯망희' is pronounced similar to the word '방망이', which means 'bat'.*

#### Explanation

```
    Initial  Medial   Final  Explanation
----------------------------------------
밯
    ㅂ                       Push to current stack (defaults to (none) stack)
                      ㅎ       from input as character (it will be saved as integer)
             ㅏ              Move cursor by one character right
----------------------------------------
망
    ㅁ                       Pop from current stack
                      ㅇ       to output as integer (it will be saved as integer)
             ㅏ              Move cursor by one character right
----------------------------------------
희
    ㅎ                       Terminates program
             ㅢ                (not executed)
```

---

### Length 4

```
박빠나망
```

One sad point about Aheui is there is no shorter expression for the integer 1. So we need two numbers and calculate with them.
Since this program has no termination command, it will print 1 infinitely.

#### Explanation

```
    Initial  Medial   Final  Explanation
----------------------------------------
박
    ㅂ                       Push to current stack (defaults to (none) stack)
                      ㄱ       the integer 2
             ㅏ              Move cursor by one character right
----------------------------------------
빠
    ㅃ                       Duplicate top number of current stack
             ㅏ              Move cursor by one character right
----------------------------------------
나
    ㄴ                       Pop two numbers from current stack
                               divide second number to first number
                               push result to current stack
             ㅏ              Move cursor by one character right
----------------------------------------
망
    ㅁ                       Pop from current stack
                      ㅇ       to output as integer
             ㅏ              Move cursor by one character right
                               (If cursor reaches the end of code space, it wraps)
                               (So in this case, cursor will go to 박 again)
```

---

### Length 5

```
바뱍멍다뼈
```

It simply prints even numbers infinitely. It also shows how to loop Aheui programs without wrapping.

#### Explanation

```
    Initial  Medial   Final  Explanation
----------------------------------------
바
    ㅂ                       Push to current stack (defaults to (none) stack)
                               if there is no final consonant, it pushes integer 0
             ㅏ              Move cursor by one character right
----------------------------------------
뱍
    ㅂ                       Push to current stack (defaults to (none) stack)
                      ㄱ       the integer 2
             ㅑ              Move cursor by two characters right
                               (In this case, cursor will go to 다)
----------------------------------------
멍
    ㅁ                       Pop from current stack
                      ㅇ       to output as integer
             ㅓ              Move cursor by one character left
----------------------------------------
다
    ㄷ                       Pop two numbers from current stack
                               add two numbers
                               push result to current stack
             ㅏ              Move cursor by one character right
----------------------------------------
뼈
    ㅃ                       Duplicate top number of current stack
             ㅕ              Move cursor by twoe character left
                               (In this case, cursor will go to 멍)
```

If we make this program into infinite one way program, it will be:

```
바박다빠망박다빠망박다빠망박다빠망박다빠망박다빠망박다빠망박다빠망...
```

Answer (score 23):

## Lisp

#### Factoid

Lisp is defined by its unique parenthetical notation.

#### Snippet (10 chars)

```
(+ 1 1 10)
```

Ok, I know I've been using `+` for a while now, but now this will show another side of it. One time, I showed `+` with 0 parameters, then 1, and now 3. This will return `12`.

#### Snippet (6 chars)

```
(main)
```

If you're deciding to compile lisp, usually you would define the function `main`. This simply executes that. Otherwise it would throw an error.

#### Snippet (5 chars)

```
(+ 1)
```

Similarly to the three-character snippet, this adds one to nothing. It seems it should show an error, but instead, simply returns 1.

#### Snippet (4 chars)

```
(ex)
```

Because `ex` is a function not defined by default, the interpreter will throw an error.

#### Snippet (3 chars)

```
(+)
```

`+` is a function that adds all of the parameters. Because this is adding nothing to nothing, you would expect this to return an error or `nil`, but it actually returns zero.

#### Snippet (2 chars)

```
()
```

This is the shortest functional snippet. It simply returns `nil`.

#### Snippet (1 char)

```
;
```

This does absolutely nothing. It is simply a comment. There is nothing that functions in Lisp that has less than two characters. (maybe reading the Factoid would help?)

Comment: "Unique" is one word for Lisp's parentheses. I'd probably go with "excessive." :)

Comment: @Alex Say what you wish. I stand by Lisp.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I think Lisp is great. Just lots and lots of parentheses.

Comment: @Alex Lots of parentheses, but it's better than having all these parentheses, square brackets, and curly brackets all over the place.

Answer (score 23):

## Plurp

**Factoid:** Plurp is a two-dimensional programming language closely related to
><> (fish) and Befunge. It is inspired by ><>.

**1 character**

```
>
```

An infinite loop. Like in ><> and Befunge, code will wrap around in Plurp.

In fact, any command but `;` when by itself in a program would result in an infinite loop.

**2 characters**

```
1i
```

Outputs 1 indefinitely. Any number from 0 to 9 would do pretty much the same.

**3 characters**

```
)s;
```

Finally! Something interesting! This is a cat program which outputs its input.

**4 characters**

```
1~i;
```

Demonstrates the pop (`~`) function. Although this pushes `1` to the stack, it is popped and therefore the program outputs nothing.

**5 characters**

```
'a's;
```

Prints `a`. This demonstrates the string parsing function: when an `'` is encountered, the rest of the characters are pushed to the stack as character codes until another `'` is encountered. This leads to the escape for `'` being quite costly: `'39&'`

The `&` used in `'39&'` concatenates the top two numbers on the stack (`39` is `[3, 9]` but `39&` is `[39]`).

**6 characters**

```
123|i;
```

Demonstrates the right-shift function. `1`, `2`, and `3` are pushed onto the stack, then the stack is shifted right (by one position). The output of this program is "312", as the 3 wraps around.

`|` can also be replaced with `\` (the left-shift operator) to shift the stack one position left instead of right. This has a surprising number of applications in Plurp.

**7 characters**

```
8[42i];
```

Like ><>, Plurp can create multiple stacks and run operations on each stack independent of the others.

There are three different kinds of stacks - additive `[`, overlap `(`, and copy additive `{`. Stacks are classified by their behaviours when opened and closed with `]` or flattened with `f`.

Additive stacks will be empty when open (`[]`) and will add their data to the end of the next stack when closed. `4[2]i;` outputs `42`.

Overlap stacks will be empty when open and will add their data to the *beginning* of the next stack when closed. `4(2]i;` outputs `2`.

Copy additive stacks are like additive stacks, but they open with the data of the last stack already in them. `4{2+]i;` outputs `442`.

**8 characters**

```
42&"i"i;
```

Like ><>, Plurp has a register (albeit only a single one). When a `"` is encountered, the interpreter checks if the register is empty. If it is, the top value on the stack is popped and pushed into the register. Otherwise, the value in the register is popped and pushed into the stack.

Therefore, even though there are two `i` commands, only one outputs `42` because the other is called while `42` is in the register and not the stack.

**9 characters**

```
39&'|||s;
```

A quine! From all the above snippets, you have enough information to figure out how this works. The key is that string parsing wraps around in this programming language, much like all regular commands.

**Read Me**

Currently the interpreter is broken due to the addition of an infinite-loop prevention system in Khan Academy. I'm working to fix it, and once I do I will catch up with this answer!

Comment: Why is this so popular!?

Comment: Are you thinking of names yet?

Comment: No, I really need to add more programs though.

Comment: *le bump please add programs**

Comment: Hi! I've finally gotten around to re-making a working interpreter. I will be adding programs soon!

Answer (score 23):

## MarioLANG

> [MarioLANG](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MarioLANG) is a two-dimensional programming language based on Super Mario. The source code's layout is similar to a Super Mario world, however the programs written in MarioLANG when compiled looks completely like a normal application, it is even turing complete!

**Length 3 Snippet**

```
!
=
```

Mario (our parser) starts in the upper-left corner, then drops down until he hits a `=` (or floor), then he executes whatever instruction is on top of that floor. Here it's the `!` command, which tells Mario to stop walking.

**Length 5 Snippet**

```
+!
==
```

This time, Mario encounters a `+` sign, which tells him to increase the cell under the pointer by one. Once again, he encounters a `!` sign that tells him to stop.

**Length 6 Snippet**

```
++:
==
```

What good is a language that can't output? Here, Mario encounters 2 `+`s (causing the cell to have a value of 2), then a `:` which outputs the numeric value of the cell under the pointer. This program will output 2. Also, note there is no floor: Mario falls until EOF where he stops.

**Length 7 Snippet**

```
+):
===
```

This should output 1 - right? No, it outputs 0. That's because the `)` command moves the pointer right one cell, like `>`in Brainf**k. `(` does the same thing, but to the left instead.

**Length 9 Snippet**

```
 >!
>^=
==
```

Mario can also jump! When he encounters the `^` jump command, Mario will move up one space. There is also the `>` command to make him go right onto the next platform.

**Length 11 Snippet**

```
[@+:@
=====
```

Two new commands are introduced: `[` and `@`. `[` tells Mario to skip the next instruction if the cell pointer is 0. `@` tells Mario to walk the other way. Here, Mario sees the `[`, and since the cell is 0, he skips the `@`. Then he adds one to the cell (`+`), outputs the number (`:`), and walks the other way `(@)`. This is an infinite loop.

**Length 13 Snippet**

```
++
==
:+<
 ==
```

Mario can also walk in different directions: the `<` command tells Mario to walk left. The 3 `+`s add 3 to the cell, and the `:` outputs `3`. Once again, Mario falls until EOF.

**Length 15 Snippet**

```
! 
#

>++:
"===
```

Going down, Mario?

The `#` and `"` commands are elevators: `#` is the start, where Mario gets on if he is not moving, and `"` is the bottom, where he gets off, we need to tell mario where to go once he come out of the pipe, so we use `>`. He then hits two `+` and a `:`, outputting 2. I've used a down elevator, but an up one would also work.

**Length 17 Snippet**

```
;
 -<
 ="
>[!
==#
```

Mariolang Can also use input. Here we use `;` to read the imput as an integer,
then we decrement our value until it reach 0, at that point we exit the loop and the program stop

Comment: Update already! This sounds pretty cool. :)

Comment: @towerofnix Had to go inactive for a while, didn't realize how popular this became. I've added 5 new snippets.

Answer (score 23):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth)

Labyrinth is my new two-dimensional programming language. I'm unreasonably proud of how it turned out, so I figured this would be a good place to introduce it and maybe popularise it a bit.

**Factoid**

Labyrinth is a 2D stack-based language without any control flow commands. Instead, control flow is determined by the layout of the source code, which is supposed to resemble a maze (hence the name).

**Length 1 snippet**

```
'
```

Every command in Labyrinth is a single character and occupies a "cell" in the 2D source code. Let's start with the latest addition to the language, because it's useful during programming and because it let's me get some basics out of the way.

The command `'` is normally just a no-op, but when the interpreter is invoked with `-d` (debug mode), `'` prints debug information about the current state. This information includes the grid (i.e. the source code; we'll see later why this is useful), the position of the IP, the moving direction of the IP, as well as the stacks. This is all the state there is in Labyrinth.

What stacks? Labyrinth operates on two stacks, "main" and "auxiliary". They both initially hold an infinite amount of zeroes, and can hold arbitrary signed integers. I picture them with the tops facing each other, growing towards the centre, i.e.:

```
Main [ ... 0 0 1 3  |  -123 345 1 0 0 ... ] Auxiliary
```

where `...` represents the infinite amount of zeroes at the bottom. This is also how they are printed by `'` and how some operator symbols have been chosen.

One last detail: Labyrinth doesn't terminate unless the IP hits a specific command. In a 1-cell program, the IP will instead repeatedly execute that one cell. This means the above program is simply an infinite loop that never prints anything. If we switch on debug mode, the code will instead repeatedly print

```
Grid:
'
Position: (0,0)
Direction: East
Main [   |   ] Auxiliary
```

Note that both stacks are currently empty (the infinite amount zeroes is, of course, not printed but implied).

**Length 2 snippet**

```
[]
```

What's this? *I don't know yet.* `[` and `]` are the only two non-letter characters which don't have an assigned function yet (and letters won't get any). So currently these are "walls" just like spaces and letters. A program which consists only of walls is considered empty and terminates immediately.

**But:** I am planning to add commands for these two characters eventually, and this snippet serves as a placeholder until then. **I'm happy to receive suggestions** what these two characters should do! If you have an idea let me know [in The Nineteenth Byte](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) or the dedicated [Labyrinth chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27364/labyrinth).

**Length 3 snippet**

Okay, real code now...

```
90.
```

Let's take a nap... this code prints an infinite stream of `ZZZZZZZ...`. There are two things of note here:

First, in languages where each character is a separate command you can often only push numbers in the range `0..9` and have to build larger numbers with arithmetic. This can get annoying, so in Labyrinth instead, a digit will multiply the top of the stack by 10 and then add itself. This lets you write out numbers in decimal in the code. [Emmental](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Emmental) has this feature as well. So `90` will actually create a 90 on the stack for `.` to print as the character `Z`.

Second, as opposed to many other 2D languages, the edges of Labyrinth's source code don't wrap around. So the IP hits a dead end after executing `.`. When this happens, the IP simply turns around and continues in the opposite direction. So the IP keeps bouncing back and forth in the source code, executing

```
90.090.090.090.090...
```

and so on, repeatedly printing `Z`.

**Length 4 snippet**

```
4!\@
```

Printing is important, so Labyrinth comes with two more commands in addition to `.`. `!` prints the integer value in decimal (as opposed to treating it as a character code). Note that it *doesn't* print a newline. But printing newlines is quite a common task, and having to do `_10.` each time is annoying, so there's `\` which just prints a single newline.

I'm also introducing `@` here. This terminates the program, so we don't have to keep writing infinitely-looping code. So this snippet happens to print its length `4`, a newline and then exits cleanly.

**Length 5 snippet**

I think we can spare a newline now:

```
?
~!@
```

`?` is the input-equivalent of `!`: it reads as many bytes from STDIN as it can to form a valid (signed) integer and pushes it onto the main stack.

Now the IP can't move to the right, because there's a wall there (spaces and letters except `v` are walls; the source code is implicitly padded to a rectangular area with spaces). However, the IP can move down so that's what it does. This is essentially the dead-end rule from snippet 3: if there is only one non-wall neighbour, move there. (From now on "neighbour" will always imply "non-wall neighbour").

`~` computes the binary NOT of the top of the stack. The IP hits another wall. However, this time it's not a dead end. It doesn't have to turn around, but it can take a left turn, so that's what it does instead. `!` prints the newly computed value, `@` ends the program.

This turning behaviour is important, so here are the exact rules for when the current cell has exactly two neighbours:

- If the IP can keep moving straight ahead, it does.
- Otherwise, the IP moves such that it doesn't reverse direction.

These two rules allow the IP to follow any "corridors" of code, even around bends. There is one more subtle special case for two neighbours, but we'll get to that later.

**Length 6 snippet**

```
,)@
.(
```

Our first *real* program. Those 6 bytes implement `cat`. `,` is to `?` what `.` is to `!`: it reads a single byte from STDIN and pushes its value onto the stack. When we hit EOF, it pushes `-1` instead. I have borrowed `(` and `)` from CJam: they decrement and increment the top of the stack respectively.

But the most important thing about this snippet is what happens after the read byte has been incremented by `)`. This time, the current cell has three neighbours: the one we came from, one straight ahead (the `@`) and one which requires a right-turn (the `(`). So where do we go?

For these kinds of junctions (3 or 4 neighbours), the top of the main stack is examined (but not popped). If it's zero, the IP continues moving straight ahead. If the top value is negative, it takes a left-turn. If it's positive, it takes a right-turn. In the case of 3 neighbours, any of those decisions might hit a wall: in that case the opposite direction is picked. This little mechanic is *the* way to implement control flow in Labyrinth.

And what happens in this specific case? As long as we're reading bytes (which will be 0 or greater), the `)` increments the value to a positive number so we take a right turn. `(` decrements it back to its original value before it's printed with `.` and we move on to reading the next byte. At EOF, the `)` will increment the `-1` to `0`, so the IP moves straight ahead, leaves the loop, hits the `@` and terminates the program. Nifty, isn't it? :)

**Length 7 snippet**

```
<.$,23>
```

We've seen in 3 how we can write simple endless loops, but the problem is the IP bounces back and forth. Not every code can easily be written such that it will still do the right thing if ran as a palindrome. Can we write similarly simple (i.e. linear) loops which just run each command once per iteration, but still put them on a single line?

For that, let me give you a glimpse at Labyrinth's second major feature (the first being how control flow works). It has four commands `<`, `>`, `^`, `v` which can modify the source code at runtime. Each of them pops one value from the main stack and then rotates (i.e. shifts cyclically) a particular row or column of the grid by a single cell. If the IP is on the row or column that is being shifted, it moves with the shift, *potentially through the edges of the grid*. This shift does not affect the IP's current orientation, and the IP will still make its normal move afterwards. I'm not aware of any other language where source code manipulation works like this.

So let's look at this code again. We start on `<`, which pops a `0` from main. The `0` indicates that the IP's own row is being shifted (to the left). So we get this code:

```
.$,23><
```

But the IP is now at the right end of the grid. It can only move left so it does. Next it hits `>`, which shifts the source code back in place:

```
<.$,23>
```

The IP is *still* at the right end, moving left. Now it executes the actual content of the loop, `32,$.`: push a `32`, read a byte, bitwise XOR, write the byte.

What does this do? If the program receives a stream of letters on STDIN, it will change the case of each letter and print them to STDOUT. E.g. `abCdE` turns into `ABcDe`. If we reach EOF on STDIN the program will terminate with an error, but let's not worry about that.

I will try to show some more elaborate use of the grid rotation commands in later snippets.

**Length 8 snippet**

```
"
:-"
~"
```

You should actually consider this one a *snippet*, not a full program. Assume that the IP enters this from the top and will leave to the right. Let's see what it does:

As mentioned in the first snippet, `"` is a no-op. It can be used to lay out paths of the Labyrinth without affecting the stacks.

`:` duplicates the top of the main stack. If that value is non-zero, the IP will take a left-turn towards the `-`, which subtracts the two values. Since they are both the same, this gives zero and the IP leaves the snippet to the right.

If the duplicated value is zero instead, the IP moves further down. `~` takes the bitwise NOT, turning `0` into `-1`. The IP then follows the bend through the no-op, onto the `-`. Now this computes `0 - (-1)`, i.e. `1`. The top of the stack is now positive and the IP takes a right-turn and leaves the snippet in the same direction as before.

In summary, this turns non-zero values into `0`, and zeroes into `1`. It is therefore a very compact implementation of logical NOT.

**Length 9 snippet**

```
 "
"_;
 ;
```

Again, consider this a snippet. The IP enters it from *either* the left *or* the top.

A well-known problem in 2D languages is the [wire-crossing problem](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Wire-crossing_problem). While Labyrinth doesn't *need* wire-crossing (or source manipulation) to be Turing complete, being able to cross paths of the Labyrinth can be very helpful when laying out the code.

There are several ways to cross "wires" in Labyrinth, and this snippet is the simplest one. `_` pushes a zero onto the main stack (this command is also necessary to push new numbers on the stack, because all the digits, including `0` just change the value of the to of the stack). So no matter whether the IP enters from the left or the top, the main stack will hold a `0` when the IP reaches the intersection. This means the IP will travel straight ahead. `;` discards the top of the main stack, in order to return to the previous state.

**Length 10 snippet**

```
_v"
 "
 )"
```

Consider this a snippet, but be aware that the height of the full source code should not be greater than three lines. The snippet is entered at the top left (on the `_`, going east) and exited either at the top right or bottom right (going east). The snippet also assumes that there's a `0` on top of the main stack.

I mentioned in snippet 5 that there's one more case to be considered for control flow when the current cell has two neighbours. Let's see what happens here:

The `_` pushes another zero onto the stack. Now the stack rotation `v` pops that zero and shifts the current column down by one, taking the IP with it:

```
_)"
 v
 ""
```

Now the IP is still facing east, and the current cell has two neighbours, above and below. This means the IP can neither move straight ahead, nor could it reverse its direction, so in principle both choices are valid. If the top of the main stack was non-zero, we'd apply the same rules as for three or four neighbours: for a negative value turn left (north), for a positive value turn right (south). But the top of the main stack *is* zero. In this particular case, the direction is chosen *randomly* (choosing uniformly between the two options). This is Labyrinth's built-in PRNG. It's quite tricky to use, because the required conditions on the IP can *only* be set up with the grid rotation commands, and it only makes a binary decision, but [it can be used](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth/blob/master/examples/rng.lab) to build up larger random numbers with some effort.

Now that the IP has chosen a random direction, what happens next? If it goes up, the zero on the stack is incremented to `1` and the IP takes a right turn and leaves the snippet at the top. If the IP went down instead, the zero remains unchanged and the IP leaves the snippet at the bottom. So this snippet can be used to either a) just generate a random bit on the stack or b) choose one of two execution paths at random (or both).

Comment: The use of digits as operators *that also work for creating multi-digit numbers* is incredibly smart! I'll keep that in mind when designing future esolangs. +1 'cause I'd like to see more. :)

Comment: I'm gonna have to learn this language, it looks like it'd be fun to golf in. +1 because I'd like to see what it can really do.

Comment: I have some ideas for `[` and `]`. They could be used for bit-shifting. They could be used for some sort of crazy goto (maybe one pops twice and goes to those coordinates on the grid, and maybe the other goes to 0,0 always). You could change all of the arithmetic to be floating point and `[`,`]` could be floor and ceiling. Just some ideas. I love the language, btw!

Answer (score 23):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL)

#### Factoid

MATL is a **stack-oriented** language based on MATLAB and suitable for code golf. Many functions are similar to those of MATLAB, sometimes with extended funcionality.

To simplify stack handling there are **clipboards**, similar to variables in other languages. An interesting feature is an automatic clipboard that holds the inputs of recent function calls. This often avoids the need to manually copy.

There are different types of functions. Most are **normal functions**, which perform operations on inputs and produce outputs. Other types are stack-handling functions, for duplicating, deleting or moving elements in the stack; and clipboard functions, for copying and pasting elements from the clipboards.

#### Length 1: sum of elements in an array

The program ([try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=cw&input=WzEgMiAzIDQ7IDUgNiA3IDg7IDkgMTAgMTEgMTJd))

```
s
```

computes the sum of an array provided as input and displays it. This serves to illustrate several things:

- **Input** can be **implicit**: if a function needs an input that is not present in the stack, it is automatically taken. The explicit form would be `is`, where `i` takes the input.
- The stack contents are **implicitly displayed** at the end of the program, by default.
- MATL, like MATLAB, has many operations that automatically operate on the contents of an array. Using terminology of other languages, `s` folds the addition operation over the array.
- If the input to `s` is multidimensional, this function performs the sum along the first non-singleton dimension, as in MATLAB. For example, if the input is a 3×4 array (use `;` as row separator), the output will be a 1×4 row array (sum along first dimension). If the input is a 1×4 row array, the result will be a 1×1 array (sum along second dimension), which is the same as a number.

#### Length 2: sum along columns

So what if we want the sum of each column, even if the input happens to be a row array? The following code ([try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WHM&input=WzEgMiAzXQ)) does that:

```
Xs
```

These **two characters** together are the name of a single function, which in this case is "sum along the first dimension". Functions are always named by either one or two characters, and in the latter case the first character is always `X`, `Y` or `Z`.

Another form of forcing the sum to operate along the fixed dimension would be to use the `s` function with two inputs, and specify the desired dimension as second input (see length-3 snippet).

#### Length 3: ternary range

```
3$:
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MyQ6&input=NQoyCjEy)

Many functions can take a variable number of inputs or outputs. Each function has a default number of inputs and outputs, or arity. These default can be modified by means of **meta-functions**. The meta-function `$` specifies the number of inputs (or even their position in the stack) of the following normal function.

The function `:` (range) by default takes one input `n`, and produces its unary range. With three inputs, say `i`, `s` and `f`, it produces an array formed by numbers `i, i+s, i+2*s`, ... up to the largest integer not exceeding `f`.

#### Length 4: multiplication table

The code ([try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OnQhKg&input=MTA))

```
:t!*
```

produces an `n`×`n` multiplicaton table, where `n` is an input number.

- `:` by default it takes 1 input, and produces the row array `[1,2,...,n]`.
- `t` is a **stack-handling function**. It also takes 1 input by default, and simply duplicates it. Other stack-handling functions are `w` (swap elements) and `b` ("bubble up" and element).
- `!` is transposition, so the row array at the top of the stack becomes a column array `[1;2;...;n]`.
- `*` corresponds to multiplication. By default it takes two inputs. Like most arithmetic operators, it works **element-wise** with **broadcast**.

The latter means that repetition is implicitly applied along singleton dimensions if needed. In this case, the two arrays have non-matching dimensions `1`×`n` and `n`×`1`. Thus the first array is implicitly replicated `n` times along the first dimension, and the second along the first dimension, so that they can be multiplied element-by-element. This produces all "combinations" (in the sense of Cartesian product) of the operation.

The result is a 2D numeric array. Numeric arrays are displayed as numbers separated by spaces with vertical alignment.

#### Length 5: display "all" even numbers

```
`@EDT
```

This uses an **infinite loop**, specifically a "do...while" loop in which the loop condition is always true. [Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YEBFRFQ&input=) (but kill it immediately).

A "do...while" loop begins with `` ` `` and ends with `]`. "End" statements `]` at the end of the program can be omitted, because the loop is **implicitly closed** in that case.

In a "do...while" loop, when the (possibly implicit) statement `]` is reached the top of the stack is consumed, and if it's truthy the code proceeds with the next iteration. An array is **truthy** if and only if it is **non-empty** and **all** its elements have **nonzero** real part. In this case a `T` literal (`true`, corresponding to a logical `1`) is pushed at the end of each iterartion, so the loop goes on forever.

The body of the loop pushes the iteration index with `@`. Note that iteration indices start at `1`. Then `E` doubles that number, and `D` displays it. In this case we cannot rely on implicit display at the end of the program, because this program never ends.

#### Length 6: Separate primes from non-primes

```
tZp2#)
```

This code accepts as input an array of positive integers, and produces two arrays: one with the primes contained in the input, and one with the non-primes. [Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dFpwMiMp&input=WzEgMiAzIDQgNSA2IDcgOCA5IDEwXQ)

The code is based on **logical indexing**, which means using an array of type `logical` as an index. This works as in MATLAB:  `true` values in the index specify which entries to use. So for an array `[10 20 30 40]`, the index `[false true false true]` refers to the subarray formed by the second and fourth entries, that is, `[20 40]`.

If we wanted to only pick the primes from the input, the code would be `tZp)`: duplicate the input (`t`), check for each entry if it's a prime (`Zp`), and then use the second array as an index into the first (`)`).

`)` is one of the several **indexing functions** in MATL. Specifically, it does **reference indexing**, which means extracting elements from an array. (This contrasts with assignment indexing, whereby specified positions of an array are written with new values). The `)` function, like others used for reference indexing, has a two-output version, which produces the indexed array and the **"complementary" array**, corresponding to the entries not selected by the index. The meta-function `#` specifies the number of outputs of the following normal function. So in this case `2#)` produces the primes and then the non-primes in separate arrays.

#### Length 7: Separate digits from non-digit characters

```
t4Y2m&)
```

This snippet is similar to that with length 6, but serves to illustrate two new aspects: predefined literals and meta function `&`. The code takes a string and separates it into two strings: one formed by the digits and one with the non-digits, maintainig the order they have in the input. [Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dDRZMm0mKQ&input=J1RoaXMgc3RyMW5nIGMwbnRhaW5zIDMgZGlnaXRzJw)

`Y2` is one of several functions that produce **predefined literals** depending on its numeric input. In this case, `4Y2` gives the string `'0123456789'`. Function `m` takes two inputs by default, and outputs a logical array that contains `true` for elements of the first input that are present in the second. This is then used as logical index into the original string, which was duplicated (`t`) at the beginning.

`2#)` would then produce a substring with the digits and then a substring with the remaining characters. But `&)` can be used instead.

Most functions allow an **alternative** or **secondary default** input/output configuration. **Meta-function `&`** is used for this purpose. For `)`, using `&` corresponds to selecting two outputs, so `&)` is equivalent to `2#)`. Thus the code produces the stated result.

The meaning of `&` is function-specific. For example, for `:` it affects the number of inputs. A way to see this is to display the **function's help** using option `-h` of the compiler:

```
>> matl -h :
:   vector of equally spaced values
    1--3 (1 / 2);  1
    colon (with three inputs x, y, z produces x:y:z; with two inputs 
    x, y produces x:y). If one input: produces 1:x
```

The line `1--3 (1 / 2);  1` describes the possible numbers of inputs and outputs. This function takes a variable number of inputs from `1` to `3`, and produces `1` output. The default number of inputs is `1`, and the effect of `&` is to change that to `2`.

#### Length 8: filter square-free numbers

The code

```
"@YfdA?@
```

takes an array of integers and outputs those integers that are square-free. A number is square-free if it can't be divided by a perfect square other than 1. Equivalently, in the prime factor decomposition of a square-free number no prime appears more than once. This code serves to illustrate some **control flow** structures, namely `for` loops and `if` branches. [Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=IkBZZmRBP0A&input=WzEwIDIwIDMwIDQwIDUwIDYwXQ)

Statement `"` begins a **for-each loop**: it takes an array as input and iterates over its columns. Within the loop, `@` pushes the current iteration variable, that is, each column of array. In the present case the input is a row array, so each column is just one number. `Yf` takes that number and pushes its prime factors. `d` computes the differences between consecutive elements, so a square-free number will not produce any `0`. `A` with a vector as input gives `true` if all the elements are nonzero. So the output of `A` tells if the current number is square-free or not.

Following is an **if branch**: `?` takes an input and if truthy executes the next statements. In this case there is only one statement, `@`, which pushes the current number (which was found to be square-free).

Control flow structures are normally ended by `]`. In this case, the two `]` statements are implicit at the end (as in the length-5 snippet). Using the compiler with the `-e` option shows the code including the implicit statements, as well as **automatic comments**, which may be useful as a starting point for an explanation of the code, with **indentation**:

```
>> matl -e "@YfdA?@

"          % for
  @        % for loop variable
  Yf       % prime factors
  d        % difference
  A        % all
  ?        % if
    @      % for loop variable
           % (implicit) end
           % (implicit) end
           % (implicit) convert to string and display
```

#### Length 11: Matrix multiplication, manually

```
7L&!*Xs6Be!
```

This illustrates the use of **multidimensional arrays**. These are a powerful tool, specially when coupled with dimension **permuting**  and broadcasting. The code takes two matrices and computes their matrix product (which could also be computed with the `Y*` function). [Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=N0wmISpYczZCZSE&input=WzEgMiAzOyA0IDUgNl0KWzMgNCA1IDY7IC00IDMgMiAwOyAtNCAtNSA2IDhdIA)

Function `7L` pushes the predefined literal `[2 3 1]`, and `&!` applies that permutation of dimensions to the first (implicit) input. Let this input be an *M*×*N* matrix (2D numerical array). The permutation with `[2 3 1]` means that the 2nd dimension becomes the first, the 3rd becomes the second, and the 1st becomes the third. Since the input is a matrix, its 3rd dimension is actually a **singleton dimension**, that is, the size along that dimension is 1. In fact, any array can be assumed to have arbitrarily many trailing singleton dimensions. So the input matrix can be interpreted as an *M*×*N*×1 3D array, which after the permutation becomes an *N*×1×*M* array.

Function `*` takes a second (implicit) input and multiplies it by the previously obtained 3D array. The multiplication is element-wise with broadcast (see length-4 snippet). The second input has size *N*×*P*, or equivalently *N*×*P*×1, and the result of `*` has size *N*×*P*×*M*. To obtain the matrix product, a sum is carried out along the first dimension using `Xs`. Note that the first dimension of the *N*×*P*×*M* array corresponds to columns of the first matrix and rows of the second matrix. The result of `Xs` has size 1×*P*×*M*.

`6B` pushes 6 in binary, that is, the logical array `TTF` (or `[true true false]`). Then `e` is applied to collapse the first two dimensions of the 1×*P*×*M* array. This works as follows. `e` is used for **reshaping** arrays, and takes two inputs by default. With a logical array as second input, it collapses consecutive dimensions of the first input that have the same logical value in the second. So in this case it collapses the first and second dimensions, producing a *P*×*M* matrix.

Finally `!` transposes the matrix to yield the *M*×*P* final result.

#### Length 12: show a simple image

The code

```
:i:!+t0)/3YG
```

takes two inputs and shows the following image (example for inputs `200`, `150`). Try it at [MATL online!](https://matl.suever.net/?code=%3Ai%3A%21%2Bt0%29%2F3YG&inputs=200%0A150&version=19.7.1)

[image]

`:` takes an input `w` and generates the row vector `[1 2 ... w]`. `i:!` takes a second input `h` and produces the column vector `[1; 2; ...; h]`. `+` creates an `h`×`w` matrix with all pair-wise additions.

`t0)` creates a copy of the matrix and extracts its last element. This uses **linear indexing**: a single index is used to access a two-dimensional array (matrix) in **column-major** order, i.e. down, then across. So for a `2`×`3` array the linear indices would be

```
1 3 5
2 4 6
```

The index is interpreted in **modular** sense. This means that indices out of bounds are interpreted cyclically. The period of the cycle is the size of the indexed dimension; or, for linear indexing, the total number of elements of the array. So in the `2`×`3` example a linear index `8` is the same as `2`. `0` always corresponds to the last value in linear order, that is, last column and last row.

Thus `t0)` is the last element of the `h`×`w` matrix of pair-wise additions. By construction, this is the largest value. So the following `/` normalizes the array to maximum value `1`. Finally, `YG` is a function for **displaying or saving images**. It takes two inputs by default, and the last input specifies what the function actually does. `3` means that the function displays the matrix (first input) with each entry corresponding to one pixel on the screen, using a grey colormap by default.

Comment: .......5 and 6?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ :-) 5 is almost ready. I hope I'll have time tomorrow!

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ 5 included. Currently thinking about 6...

Comment: 7, 8, 9, 10, 11?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Working on that :-)

Comment: ouch wut a pain, lemme thirteenfold it for you :D

Comment: @Agawa001 Manual matrix multiplication added :-)

Comment: @CalculatorFeline I've added some snippets

Comment: 13, 14, 15, 16?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 I haven't had any idea for those yet... :-)

Answer (score 22):

## Kotlin

Kotlin is a statically-typed programming language that runs on the Java Virtual Machine and also can be compiled to JavaScript source code. Its primary development is from a team of JetBrains programmers based in Saint Petersburg, Russia.

Factoid: The name comes from the Kotlin Island, near St. Petersburg.

**Length 1 `?`**

Kotlin has built-in null safety. A normally declared variable cannot contain a null value, unless that type is declared with the modifier `?`. For example, `var a: String = "sam"; a = null` is an error at runtime. However, `var a : String? = "sam"; a = null` is legal.

This extends to parameters, where a possibly-null variable cannot be used where a not-null variabled has been specified.

**Length 2 `?.`**

Kotlin allows us to chain methods together, with a short cut for nulls. So, if we did `val myBoss = employee?.department?.boss?.name` then, if any of the intermediate calls were null, the final result would be null and not a null pointer exception.

**Length 3 `out`**

Kotlin supports declaration site variance like Scala, but using the `out` keyword rather than +. In scala, `trait Foo[+T]` makes Foo covariant in T, in Kotlin the equivilent would be `trait Foo[out T]`, similar to how C# does it. The idea being that a covariant type only produces values of T (outputs them), so the naming convention makes it easier to remember which way around co-variance and contra-variance work.

**Length 4 `data`**

The `data` keyword is used to create a data class. Eg, `data class Foo(val a: String, val b: Int)`. The compiler automatically generates the following functions from all properties declared in the primary constructor with a val or var: `equals()` / `hashCode()` pair, `toString()` of the form "Foo(a="qwerty", b=42)", `componentN()` functions corresponding to the properties in their order or declaration, and a `copy()` function.

If any of these functions are manually defined in the class body or inherited from non trivial parent types, they will not be generated.

**Length 5 `c.foo`**

Extension methods are methods that can be added to an already existing type. To declare an extension function, we need to prefix the name of the method with the type we wish to extend. Eg, the following adds a method to String called take:

```java
fun String.take(k : Int) {
 ....
}
```

Note, `this` inside the function refers to the receiver object. Eg, when invoking `string.take(4)` the `this` would refer to the string instance.

**Length 6: `inline`**

We can ask Kotlin compiler to inline a function, so that the overhead of wrapping a closure in an object does not occur.

Eg, given

```java
inline fun lock<T>(lock: Lock, body: () -> T): T {
  // ...
}
```

Then

```java
lock(l) {foo()}
```

Would be compiled into

```java
lock.lock()
try {
  foo()
}
finally {
  lock.unlock()
}
```

**Length 7: `a !is B`**

Kotlin does not require explicit casts, but instead will smart-cast a type once an `is` or `!is`check is performed. For example:

```java
// given a x of type Object
if (x is String) {
   println(x.substring(3)) // x is automatically cast to String
}
```

Now get this; the compiler is even smart enough to understand negative casts that lead to a return. For example:

```java
// given a x of type Object
if (x !is String) return
// from here, x is available as a String
println(x.substring(3))
```

That's pretty cool.

Also Kotlin does allow unsafe casting if needed, using the `as` keyword. It will throw an exception if the cast cannot be performed. Eg,

```java
val y : String = x as String
```

**Length 8: `when (x)`**

When is somewhere between simple switching and pattern matching. A `when` block will match its argument against each branch until some branch condition is satisfied. The `when` block is an expression so yields a value. The default case is declared with the `else` keyword but is not needed if the compiler can see that all cases are covered. One difference with Scala here is that the branches can invoke method calls directly (with Scala we would move that to a guard clause on the case branch).

An example:

```java
val k :String = ... // some string

when (k) {
  isUppercase(k) ->
  isLowercase(k) ->
  else ->
}
```

Answer (score 22):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com)

(View them [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lnpepfxpbh)!)

### 17-vote

```
\frac{d}{dx}x^4+x
```

Derivatives!

### 16-vote

```
\prod _{n=1}^x n
```

This is the factorial function, using a product instead of `x!`.

### 15-vote

```
\left[xx\right]
```

FINALLY! We have a bracketted equation! This is a single-element array containing the equation `x*x`.

### 14-vote

```
\frac{-3}{x^2}
```

This is a fraction with `-3` on top and `x^2` on top.

### 13-vote

```
-x^2/\cos x^2
```

*Where are your parents now!* This creates a sick-looking equation.

### 12-vote

```
x^x+y^y=xxy
```

This equation shows all possible values for which the above holds true. This tells us that Desmos can show an extreme amount of detail, and is not your average calculator.

### 11-vote

```
ex^2-x=\pi
```

(note the trailing space) This solves for the variable `x`, that is, `x = -0.90673034 or 1.2746098`.

### 10-vote

```
r=.5\theta
```

(There is a trailing space, mandatory as per [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7075/does-desmos-com-count-as-a-programming-language/7077#7077)) This creates a lovely parametric equation i.e. tight-ish spiral.

### 9-vote

```
3x\ge 4y^2
```

Desmos supports inequalities of nonlinear quality! This produces the inequality 3*x* ≥ 4*y*<sup>2</sup> and graphs it.

### 8-vote

```
\theta _2
```

This shows that Desmos supports the explicit `\theta` variable, which prints like this: *θ*. The `_2` is a subscript, so the full result would look like this: *θ*<sub>2</sub>. This formula also shows a quirk of how bytes are counted in Desmos: though the space could be removed and still have the same copy-and-paste result, the result that is copied from Desmos forms the byte count. This will also explain why no results with parentheses, etc., have thus been posted; since copying a pair of parentheses would result in `\left(\right)`, a 13-byte expression, these will not be posted until around ~14+ votes.

### 7-vote

```
\cos bx
```

When Desmos encounters an undefined variable, Desmos creates a small popup:

[image]

When you click on that button, the following formula will be inserted in the slot after the original function:

[image]

Pressing the play button will allow you to "phase" through values of `b`, seeing the display update. Check the link above to observe this behaviour. This also shows Desmos's support for implicit parenthesis in a trigonometric function, so long as all of its inputs are "attached" with multiplication or division operators. (The latter only happens when directly copy+pasting the code into the editor.)

### 6-vote

```
\sin x
```

Desmos supports trigonometric functions, defined like that in (La)TeX. This draws a graph, as the variable *x* is taken to mean an equation variable.

### 5-vote

```
x=y^2
```

A function of y… how cool is that!? Something your ol' TI-84 can't do…

### 4-vote

```
2x^3
```

This is an implicit definition of an equation (implied is `f(x)`). This draws the graph of aforementioned function. (Also shows that Desmos will interpret a number next to a variable to mean multiplication, that is, coefficient multiplication.)

### 3-vote

```
a=5
```

Desmos supports the definition of variables.

### 2-vote

```
.3
```

Desmos supports decimal numbers without the leading zero.

### 1-vote (thanks!)

```
7
```

Numeric literal. Comment: Up until about 5-7 votes, you'll be getting interesting numbers.

### 0-vote

Desmos is an online graphing tool to help those in the mathematical field to visualize problems like trigonometry, basic derivation, and even 3D graphs!

Comment: Judging from the snippets so far, I don't know what you can do with less than about twenty characters, but impress me.

Comment: @ThomasKwa Thanks ^_^ I will.

Comment: [Link for the interested](https://www.desmos.com/)

Answer (score 22):

### [AppleScript (or osascript, from command line)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html)

#### Factoid

Applescript is a programming language most commonly used for automating events in the system environment and Aqua interface interactions in Mac OS X, though it can be used as a normal programming language as well. Its syntax boasts an (almost) English grammar method of writing, making it easy-to-use for programmers, beginners or otherwise.

#### Length 1 Snippet

`1`

Okay, it looks a little boring.

Basically, this is a *very* short operation. I take 1 and do nothing with it. Since AppleScript always returns the result of the final operation, it will print "1" to the console.

[image: 1]

#### Length 2 Snippet

`it`

This keyword defines the current object being told to do something: if I was telling `Finder` to do something, it would return `Finder`. However, since I haven't defined anything for `it` to be tied to this is equivalent to

`me`

Which defines the top-level script object. So, at the end of the day, both of these 2-byte codes will return

`«script»`

Which is how AppleScript defines `it`self.

[image: it]

#### Length 3 Snippet

We're slowly creeping our way to show the full functionality of AppleScript...

```
{1}
```

This is the general array syntax in AppleScript. Arrays in AppleScript act more like ArrayLists in that they are not restricted as to what they may hold, and you can concatenate onto them at any time with `&`. (note that `&` is also the string concatenation symbol and in some cases may cause conflicts).

[image: array]

#### Length 4 Snippet

```
tell
```

While this code by itself won't function due to the enormous verbosity AppleScript, this is the keyword that allows the "telling" of commands to an application. This unlocks enormous potential, from the automation of GUI interactions to changing System Settings with a click of a button.

#### Length 5 Snippet

```
log""
```

This is another benefit of AppleScript: auto-complete. AppleScript is very good at golfing (not really) due to its ability to correct code. This code will not be executed. Oh no, the code that will be executed is this:

```
log ""
```

It auto-fills the space for you.

This code, as is, will print out to the "Messages" tab in Script Editor or to STDERR through `osascript -e`.

[image: log]

#### Length 6 Snippet

```
repeat
```

While this won't run on its own (it needs an `end` statement), this is one of the most important keywords in AppleScript - on its own, with no restrictions on how many times it will repeat, it will loop infinitely. [The syntax relating to repeat is immense](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.20/20.12/RepeatLoops/index.html), so I won't mention it all in this snippet. It'll come back later, though.

#### Length 7 Snippet

```
try
end
```

Error catching in AppleScript. Piece o' cake. This may be used in instances where you are comparing possible null strings to other strings or when trying to see if `true > 5`. It's also very important syntax, but used less frequently in the code golf community.

#### Length 8 Snippet

```
activate
```

Let's say you've lost the primary window of an application, or you want to start it. If you tell an application, even one that *isn't active*, to activate, it will move to the pane where it was last open (or currently open) and pull up any active windows (or start them if the application wasn't active until the point at which you told it to activate).

Example code that actually is relevant:

```
tell app"Finder"to activate
```

Runs as

```
tell application "Finder" to activate
```

Which makes the "Finder" application the primary application (for MacOSX users, this means that it's the application name in the top-left hand corner. It might have no active windows).

[image: finder]

#### Length 9 Snippet

```
keystroke
```

This is a command that's typically specific for the application 'System Events' - basically, it replicates the user of typing in a character.

[image: keystroke]

#### Length 10 Snippet

```
set x to 1
```

*Finally*.

This is how you make variables in AppleScript. Due to its verbosity, many answers for languages like CJam or Pyth will be shorter than *just the variable declaration*. This is why AppleScript will almost *never* win at golfing.

Still, though. The fact that it's also pseudocode is nice.

#### Length 11 Snippet

```
if 1<=1
end
```

A simple if statement.

This will execute as

```
if 1 ≤ 1
end if
```

Thanks to AppleScript autocorrection and bonus(!) supported characters. This is the most basic (and most concise!) syntax for if statements in AppleScript.

Note: This is actually shorter than `if <conditional> then`, the one-line way to do it.

Second note: Because of the *extreme* verbosity of AppleScript, the "correct" way to do this is with `less than or equal to`, but it will support <= or ≤ anyways.

#### Length 12 Snippet

```
current date
```

Wonder what this one does...

[image: current date]

#### Length 13 Snippet

```
the clipboard
```

You can gather the contents of the clipboard fairly simply with this command; when called anywhere, it will return the value of what's held currently in the clipboard. It's brother, `set the clipboard to`, does exactly as it sounds.

[image: clipboard]

#### Length 14 Snippet

You know a language is verbose when the first method of input through scripting is 32 bytes long.

```
clipboard info
```

I'm not even sure what this one is... The documentation about it simply says:

> Returns information about the clipboard.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

This is a result for a clipboard that has been set to `""` with the command `set the clipboard to ""`

[image: clipboard2]

#### Length 15 Snippet

Who knew AppleScript was so sassy?

```
summarize string
```

I honestly have no clue what the point of this command is. When called on datatypes, though, it does some funny things.

[image: string]

'A string is pretty much "TEXT"'

[image: cappa]

'Kappa, you don't know what an application is?'

[image: doubt]

'I'm kinda doubtful of reality.'

...and nihilistic, too? I'm learning a lot about AppleScript. >.>

Comment: seems like the "keystroke" snippet showcases the "current date" feature

Comment: @ven Whoops, I'll fix that. Thanks.

Comment: 17 votes. Please update your answer ASAP. (don't panic though)

Answer (score 21):

## [Delphi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_(programming_language)) (also known as [Object PASCAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Pascal))

**Factoid:** Over the years the name of Delphi changed prefixes many times. Beginning with *Borland Delphi*. This name held for ~13 years until it got renamed to *Embarcadero Delphi* in 2008 (as you may assume *Embarcadero* bought Delphi).
 The code is similar to C++, but is more object oriented and is translated from PASCAL to C++ during compilation. Recent versions are also able to generate applications for *all* major OSes including Windows, OSX, Linux, Android and even iOS.

*Downsides are:* Delphi is built together with VCL (Visual Component Library) which slows down the performance of graphic-heavy applications a lot (every change of properties of a visual object will cause a redraw of the component), but the IDE is even simpler to use (drag and drop of components).

> ### Notes:
>
> Because a line-ending semicolon (`;`) is optional before a closing `end;` tag, I may omit it to save characters.

### Length 1:

```
;
```

Yes, I know. It's very basic, but is compiled without throwing errors, warnings etc.
It will be compiled into a simple `NOP` statement doing nothing.
This may be helpful, if the IDE removes empty procedures, to make sure you remember to program them.

### Length 2:

### 1:

```
D;
```

This will simply run the procedure `D` without any arguments. In Delphi there is no distinction of lower- and uppercase names (functions, procedures, variables even files in the compiler directive) and functions or procedures (two different types of jumping to code and returning back) can be called as well as be declared without braces (`()`) if they don't request parameters.
<sub>This above means, that the procedure/function could be called either `d` or `D` and could be declared with or without braces. The compiler takes care of managing this.</sub>

### 2:

```
L:
```

This places a label at the current location. You can then use `goto L;` to jump to that label, which allows skipping code or alternative loops.
You just need to make sure that you declared the label in the *function/procedure* head (`label L;`)

### Length 3:

```
asm
```

Yes, Delphi allows inline assembly code!
This snippet is the opening tag for assembly code, but have to close it with `end;` of course else it will spam compiler errors.
Inside the `asm [...] end;` block you can use your beloved assembly with all the variables used in usual Delphi.

### Length 4:

```
Date
```

or

```
Time
```

Those two are *functions* returning the actual date or time of the day of the type `TDateTime`. Funny enough `TDateTime` is just an alias for `Double` with no changes *at all*. Using `DateToStr` or `TimeToStr` every `Double` can be converted into the actual Date/Time.

### Length 5:

```
Free;
```

Bam! This procedure frees the current object (ie. safely destroying it). If you do it on one of your forms this closes the window but keeps the process (event queue, primary thread etc.) running. If an object is currently being created, calling `Free;` will throw an access violation error.

### Length 6:

```
goto l
```

(Assume `l` is an already defined and set label)
Tired of `while True do` loops? Use `label`s and `goto`s!
If you put a call in the line before an `end;` you don't need a line-ending `;` (semicolon). Very handy.

### Length 7:

```
Swap(8)
```

Some bitwise operations, yay! This *function* swaps the first half of a SmallInt (16 bits) and the second half. Example: 8 (0000 0000 | 0000 1000) becomes 2048 (0000 1000 | 0000 0000).
It doesn't matter which size the integer actually has, it gets converted to a *SmallInt* by truncating/filling with zeros.

Funny side-note: Usually all functions are declared anywhere, especially when exploring their declaration, but `Swap` (as well as a few others) are not found in the source of their declaration file (*System.pas*) but the declaration is displayed correctly.

### Length 8:

```
Repaint;
```

If you call this in a component's thread (which is usually your main thread), this will schedule all child components and itself for repainting. This is usually not needed, but if you modify components outside of the main thread (eg. in a secondary thread) the components do not get invalidated nor repainted, thus needing this *procedure*.
<sub>This *procedure* also has an alias called `Refresh;`.</sub>

### Length 9:

1:

```
Trim(' ')
```

This *function* takes a string and *trims* (ie. removes) all leading/following spaces (no other character(s)) and returns the trimmed string.
There are even *functions* to *trim* only one side (left or right).

2:

```
{Comment}
```

Right, Delphi doesn't use curly brackets in code, but rather as the opening/closing tag of a comment. There are *two* types of declaring a comment:

1. curly brackets like above (`{}`).
   They allow multi-line comments. You can replace those curly brackets with `(* *)`, if you are not able to use those.
2. double forward slashes (`//`).
   Many languages feature them, so does Delphi. The end of the comment is the next line break, so use this for small notes.

### Length 10:

```
{$R *.dfm}
```

"What is this?", you might think. It seems like a comment I just characterised above.
But it isn't;
it's a compiler directive! It tells the compiler to add a file named the same as this *Unit* (that's how source files are called in *Delphi*), but with the extension `.dfm`, which is the common file type of a form.
Compiler directives can be identified by the `$` as the first character in curly brackets.

### Length 11:

```
SendToBack;
```

Some more things you can do with windows/forms you have control of (which should be all of them; unless the system denies permission, which may happen on windows owned by processes of the *System* user).
This *procedure* will put the window to the back of the stack without losing focus. This may be useful for something, but hiding a form/window moves the focus to the next one and doesn't keep the actual window open and focused.

Answer (score 21):

## CSS

#### Length 18 snippet

```css
(min-width: 700px)
```

This is part of a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), which allows certain styles to only show for certain media. Perhaps the most common is min- and max-width, which is the basis of responsive web design, allowing the site to look different depending on the device width. While a news site might expand to fill a widescreen monitor by fitting several stories next to each other, on a phone there is only enough room for one.

The most common way of using media queries is within a stylesheet: the rules are surrounded by `{}` brackets, prefixed with `@media ([rule])`, like so: (click "Full page" to see the background color change from tomato to turquoise)

```css
body {
  background-color: tomato;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  body {
    background-color: turquoise;
  }
}
```

Media queries can also tell you even more data about a device, such as its resolution, color, and orientation.

#### Length 15 snippet

```css
input:checked
```

Another pseudo-selector, this selects all `<input>`s that are checkboxes (or radio buttons or dropdown options) that have been selected by the user. This gives CSS an unintended way to register clicks, allowing for everything from [tabs](https://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/) to [a reaction time test](http://codepen.io/bali_balo/pen/gpvVZv).

These work by having a `<label>` for the checkbox that checks the box when clicked anywhere on the text. The checkbox is hidden, leaving just the label. Then the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+` is used to select the label. Here is a simple example (click "Show code snippet").

```css
input:checked + label {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="foo" id="radio1" />
  <label for="radio1">Click me!</label>

<input type="radio" name="foo" id="radio2" checked />
  <label for="radio2">Click me!</label>

<input type="radio" name="foo" id="radio3" />
  <label for="radio3">Click me!</label>
```

#### Length 14 snippet

```css
columns:4 12em
```

CSS has the ability to break up long text into several shorter columns, as commonly found in newspapers. The `columns` property above is shorthand for `column-count: 4; column-width: 12em`, which tells the browser to break the text into at *most* 4 columns, at *least* 12em wide. There are more related properties that allow you to control other aspects, such as gap and rule between columns.

#### Length 12 snippet

```css
display:flex
```

This is the code to make flexboxes, which do just what you think: make boxes flexible. This does away with hacky methods developers used and adds a lot of functionality. [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) has an excellent guide to all things flexbox that explain them in more detail.

#### Length 11 snippet

```css
:last-child
```

This is a pseudo-class that selects each element that is the last child of its parent. For example, take the following HTML code.

```html
<section>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Bar</p>
  <p>Baz</p>
</section>
```

A selector of `p:last-child` would match the Baz paragraph because it is last. However, if there were a different element, say `<blockquote>`, after Baz, that selector would match nothing because there is no `<p>` that is the last child. For this, you would use `p:last-of-type`, which ignores all non-paragraph elements and finds only the last `<p>`, regardless of whether it is last overall.

A useful cousin of this selector is `:nth-child`. It is clear that `:nth-child(3)` would match the third element, but you can also use more complex queries, such as `:nth-child(2n+1)`, which matches every other element. This is useful for styling every other row of a long table for easy contrast. [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) lists several ways to powerfully use `nth-child`.

#### Length 10 snippet

```css
!important
```

This causes other, more specific rules to be overridden. It is placed after a declaration, before the semicolon. Note that in [most situations](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/), you should not use this, because it can make debugging a nightmare, but I will take this opportunity to talk about *[specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)*, which is where the "cascading" in CSS's name comes from.

This basically means that a declaration that applies to a few elements (i.e. it's more specific) will be used in favor of a declaration that applies to more elements. For example, take these HTML and CSS snippets (click "Run code snippet" to see what happens):

```css
.green { color: green; }
#red { color: red; }
* { color: blue; }
p { color: yellow; }
```

```html
<p class="green" id="red">Foo bar</p>
```

You'll notice that even though all three rules match the `<p>` element, the red color gets applied because it is the most specific: as mentioned below: `#red` is an ID, which should be unique to only one element, while you can have any number of `green` classes or `<p>` elements. The complete specificity order is found in the Mozilla Developer Network page linked above. In the following snippet, nothing has changed except for the addition of `!important`, but it causes the universal selector, which is the least specific, to take precedence over all the others.

```css
.green { color: green; }
#red { color: red; }
* { color: blue !important; }
p { color: yellow; }
```

```html
<p class="green" id="red">Foo bar</p>
```

#### Length 9 snippet

```css
max-width
```

This property is pretty self-explanatory: it defines the maximum width an element can have. One common example usage is for a webpage that has large amounts of text, such as a blog post or news article.  You would want the text to take up as much horizontal space as possible on any device, so you'd set the width of each paragraph element to `100%`. However, on wide screens, lines become too long to navigate comfortably, so you might set the `max-width` to `1000px` so the width stops increasing after the window is wider than 1000 pixels. Predictably, there are also `min-width` and `max-height` properties.

#### Length 8 snippet

```css
q::after
```

This creates a pseudo-element (slightly different from the pseudo-*class* in the length 6 snippet below) after every `<q>` element, which can be separately styled from the `<q>` itself. This is commonly used with the `content` property, which allows you to add text that will show up after the element. `<q>` is used to designate inline quotations, so you would add the declaration `content: '"'` to automatically add quotation marks after every quote.

As you might guess, there is also a `::before` pseudo-element which does the same thing, except before the element. The two of these working together can be used to make all sorts of shapes like a heart or star using only one HTML element and CSS (which is based on the *box* model). You can see many of these and their code on [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/).

#### Length 7 snippet

```css
b{top:0
```

This is one of the shortest possible full "programs" that can actually do something. It demonstrates the format of a CSS rule: before the braces is the selector, which is usually an HTML tag, class, or ID, but it can also be more advanced, like some of the snippets below. The `b` in this example selects every HTML `<b>` (bold text) element.

The inside of the braces are the declarations. (The closing brace of the last rule is optional.) Each declaration is a pair of property and value, separated by semicolons (again, the last semicolon is optional). In this example, `top` is the property, `0` is the value, and they are separated by a colon. A more readable and realistic version of the above would be:

```css
b {
  top: 0;
}
```

#### Length 6 snippet

```css
:hover
```

This is a pseudo-class selector that is applied when an element is hovered over with the mouse. You see this all the time, for example in comments on a Stack Exchange site that show upvote and flag buttons on hover, or links that change color when you mouse over them. There are other state selectors like active, focus, and visited.

#### Length 5 snippet

```css
[alt]
```

This is a selector to match any element with the `alt` attribute (most often used for specifying alternative text if an `img` cannot be displayed), regardless of what it is or if it is empty. You can use `[alt=foo]` to only match elements with an `alt` value of `foo`. There are several others for attributes containing, beginning with, and ending with a value.

#### Length 4 snippet

```css
#38b
```

CSS uses hex triplets to specify color, which consist of three two-digit hexadecimal numbers, two each for the amount of red, green, and blue present in the color. If both digits in each set are the same, as in `#3388bb`, it can be shortened to just the first digit of each, as in the snippet above. There are 2<sup>24</sup> = 16777216 possible colors. The color is shown below:

[image: #38b]
([source](https://placehold.it/50/08b/08b))

#### Length 3 snippet

```css
p#s
```

This matches a `<p>` (paragraph) element with the ID `s`. IDs are similar to classes, which are explained below, except classes can be used on any number of elements and an element can have multiple classes, whereas each ID should only be used once, and elements can only have one ID.

IDs can also be used as targets, where a link to an ID links directly to that element on the page. For example, a link to this question ending in `#49172` will link directly to this answer, because it has ID `49172`. You can chain IDs and classes: `.a#b.c` matches an element with ID `b` and classes `a` and `c`.

#### Length 2 snippet

```css
.a
```

This matches an element with the class `a`, used for styling multiple instances of a style. For example, you might use `<a class="external">` for styling only external links, different from all links.

#### Length 1 snippet

```css
*
```

This is the [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors). It matches any element on the page, although it is the most expensive selector.

#### Factoid

CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) is not your typical programming language, as it is used for styling HTML web pages, but I thought it still would be interesting for this challenge.

CSS came at a time when design on the Internet was a mess, with designers abusing HTML for styling purposes (`<table>` has never been the same). Adoption wasn't consistent across browsers, causing headaches for designers who had to resort to "hacks" to get their code to work cross-browser. These different implementations continue to this day, although much better, in the form of vendor prefixes.

Comment: Maybe show off your color! `![](http://dummyimage.com/100x100/38b/38b.png)`

Answer (score 20):

## [Inform 7](http://inform7.com/)

Inform 7 is a natural language based programming language for Interactive Fiction.

#### Factoid

Inform 7 is among the easiest languages to read, and was surreptitiously featured in [why the lucky stiff's printer spool book](http://www.scribd.com/doc/136875051/why-s-complete-printer-spool-as-one-book#page=53). His code and the game it compiles to [can be played online](http://playfic.com/games/waxpancake/sacred-clowns-by-why-the-lucky-stiff).

#### Length 3

```
X:Y
```

Inform 7 is a rules based language. The standard library defines many rulebooks and the player can define more. These rules are used for event handling and to create extensible procedures. Each rulebook can contain several rules, which consist of a rule *preamble*, and a body. The rule preamble is at a minimum the name of the rulebook, but it can also have many additional conditions.

In this example the rulebook preamble is the name of the rulebook `X`, and the body consists of a single phrase (function) `Y`. Inform 7 code is usually much more verbose than this, so these short examples will not be able to showcase the natural language aspects of the language ;).

#### Length 4

```
X YY
```

Each rulebook has a name and a *basis*: a variable type which is the main parameter for the rulebook. When you call a rulebook you can optionally call it for a particular value, which must match the type of the basis.

When a rulebook is called it goes through the rules in order and runs whichever rules have matching preambles. The preambles can specify that they want to run only for a particular subclass of the basis, only for values which meet a specific condition, or only for a single specific value. Rulebooks normally run all the rules with a matching preamble, but rules can stop it from continuing. The rules of a rulebook are automatically sorted in order from most to least specific so that if only one rule will be run, it will be the most specific one (though rules can be manually repositioned).

This example specifies a rule preamble for the rulebook `X`. `YY` could be either a subclass of the basis, an adjective phrase which checks whether the value matches some condition, or a particular object called `YY`.

#### Length 5

```
"[s]"
```

Here's the first example of real code! Text in Inform 7 can either be a simple literal string, or a dynamic text with substitutions which are processed at run time. Under the hood these texts are compiled to functions, but they are entirely interchangeable with simple literals.

Text substitutions can run essentially any other phrases/functions, and can be passed arguments too. Many come predefined in the base library. This example, the `to say s` phrase, will print an 's' if the last number printed was not 1. Similar substitutions can be used for entire sentences to output the correct grammatical inflections for a particular narration style (such as first person past tense or third person future tense), even allowing the narration style to be changed at run time.

Answer (score 20):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony)

Hexagony is a 2D esoteric language made by Martin Büttner based on hexagons. Not only the programs self are hexagons, but the memory model of terror is also based on hexagons. It took me quite some time to understand the model of terror, but eventually I still don't get it. First time I programmed in this, I was happy to get *anything* outputted, but after a while I realised that this is a very interesting language, with a lot to discover. I would definitely recommend programming in Hexagony.

---

#### Length 1 snippet (try it [here](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=IQ&input=))

```
!
```

Or in hexagon form:

```
!
```

Let's talk a bit about the memory model in Hexagony. Every memory edge has a standard value, `0`. This is different from some other models, which are standard `null`. The second thing which makes this memory model different, is that the data kept in the memory edges are always numbers. No strings, lists, tuples and so on. For this program, I'm  going to introduce you to the command `!`. This outputs the *decimal* representation of the current memory edge. `;` would do the same thing, but outputs the *ASCII* representation.

So, you can already expect what this is going to do. This is going to print an infinite amount of `0`. **After running in the online interpreter, immediately kill it**. It won't stop, *ever*.

---

#### Length 2 snippet (try it [here](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=IUA&input=))

```
!@
```

Or in hexagon form:

```
 ! @
. . .
 . .
```

So, you might be wondering... When can you make this stop? That is done with the `@` command. After reaching this point, the program terminates. That means we can now safely output one `0` with the program. Another thing you might be wondering is 'What are all those dots doing there?'. That brings us to the next command, the no-op `.`. When the pointer comes to a no-op, it will not do anything and continues its way in the same direction. This means that `!@` and `!@...` and `!@.....` are all the same and give the same output. However, if we add another dot: `!@......`, this would give a bigger hexagon, since the maximum amount for a two-sided hexagon is smaller than the length of the program. It would give the following:

```
  ! @ .
 . . . .
. . . . .
 . . . .
  . . .
```

---

#### Length 3 snippet (try it [here](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=OSFA&input=))

```
9!@
```

Or in hexagon form:

```
 9 !
@ . .
 . .
```

First of all, decimals in the program will be added to the current memory edge. If the memory egde = `402` and passes by a `3`, the new memory edge will contain `4023`. Same counts for letters, which replaces the memory edge with the ASCII value of the letter. I'll now explain how pointers move in Hexagony. But first of all, there isn't just one pointer. There are *six*. Each in every corner:

```
  0 . 1
 . . . .
5 . . . 2
 . . . .
  4 . 3
```

They all point clockwise, so `0` would go to the east (`E`), the `1` would go to the southeast (`SE`) and so on. The standard active pointer is `0`, and you can switch the active pointer using the `[` and the `]` command. The next thing is, what happens when they get out of the board? When they leave at a non-corner point, they will enter the board again in the other half of the program (pointer starts at `A`):

```
   . . . .        . F . .        . A . .        . . A .
  A B C D E      . . G . .      . B . . F      . . B . .
 . . . . . .    A . . H . .    . C . . G .    . . C . . G
. . . . . . .  . B . . I . .  . D . . H . .  . . D . . H .
 F G H I J K    . C . . J .    E . . I . .    . E . . I .
  . . . . .      . D . . K      . . J . .      F . . J .
   . . . .        . E . .        . K . .        . . K .
```

If the pointer leaves from a corner, it depends on what value the current memory edge has (from `A` to `B`):

```
                     memory > 0            memory <= 0

     . . A ->          . . .              -> B . .
    . . . .           . . . .               . . . .
-> B . . . .         . . . . A ->          . . . . A ->
    . . . .           . . . .               . . . .
     . . A ->       -> B . .                 . . .
```

So the order of operations in this program is `9`, `!`, `@`, which will output 9.

---

#### Length 4 snippet (try it [here](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=ISQhKQ&input=))

```
!$!)
```

Or in hexagon form:

```
 ! $
! ) .
 . .
```

First, it begins at the top left `!`, so this will output `0`. After that, it goes to the `$`, which is a jump. This will skip the next command, which is `!`. So the `0` isn't outputted twice. After that, the pointer gets to the `)`. This is an increment command, which just adds `1` to the current memory edge. After that, the pointer leaves the hexagon in the right corner and re-enters at the bottom left (see previous snippet to see why). As you can guess, this will output `012345678910111213141516171819202122232425...`.

**After running in the online interpreter, immediately kill it**, it won't stop.

---

#### Length 5 snippet (try it [here](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=ISQhKQ&input=))

```
H;i;@
```

Or in hexagon form:

```
 H ;
i ; @
 . .
```

This one is quite easy and simple. First, the pointer gets to the `H`, which pushes the char value of `H`. The `;` will output the char `H`. After that, when the pointer comes to the `i`, the value of the memory edge will be replaced by the value of `i`. This will be printed by the second `;` and terminates because of the `@`.

This will output `Hi`.

---

#### Length 6 snippet (try it [here](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=NDA7KTso&input=))

```
40;);(
```

Or in hexagon form:

```
 4 0
; ) ;
 ( .
```

The new thing here is that it appends two different numbers to the memory edge. After going through the `4` and the `0`, the memory edge has the value `40`. This is in ASCII `(`. After that, the program will output this character and adds one up to the memory edge. That gives us `41`, which is the closing parenthese (`)`). After outputting this character, the program decreases the current memory edge by 1 and goes into an infinite loop. The output will look like this: `()()()()()()()()()()...`

**After running in the online interpreter, immediately kill it**, it won't stop.

---

#### Length 7 snippet (try it [here](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=P30_IiohQA&input=NAoz))

```
?}?"*!@
```

Or in hexagon from:

```
 ? }
? " *
 ! @
```

This is where the memory model of terror begins. What this does is taking 2 integers (these have to be positive or both negative), multiplies them and outputs the result. I'll explain this with the hexagonal memory model:

[image]

In the beginning, the memory model starts at the `a`. The `?` pushes the input onto the memory edge `a`. After that, the `}` switches to the right memory edge, which is `b`. There we push the input to the memory edge `b`. The `"` moves the memory pointer backwards and to the left, which is `c`. The `*` calculates the product of the two neighbours, which are `a` and `b`, prints it and terminates.

In pseudocode:

```
a = input()
b = input()
c = a * b
print(c)
end
```

---

#### Length 8 snippet (try it [here](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=LyshPS8xfX4&input=))

```
/+!=/1}~
```

Or in hexagon form:

```
  / + !
 = / 1 }
~ . . . .
 . . . .
  . . .
```

Yes, this gives us a size 3 hexagon. That is because the program can't fit in a size 2 hexagon. In the hope to create a Fibonacci sequence, I ended up with this. It gives the following sequence:

```
11213214421574217184218758422047684222352684224400368422...
```

<s>I don't even know how this can output something. I probably made a mistake in my head or something, because I can't visualize what is actually happening.</s>

Thanks to FryAmTheEggman, this does output something Fibonacci-like:

```
1
12
132
1442
15742
171842
1875842
20476842
223526842
2440036842
```

The end part is always the same (`2`, `42`, `842`, `6842`). This is quite interesting and I'll try to find a more describable pattern.

**After running in the online interpreter, immediately kill it**, it won't stop.

Comment: I'm upvoting this, even if it means beating my answer. Hexagony is so fun!

Comment: Fibonacci can be done in [6 with no separator](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62716/31625), and [18 with](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65017/31625), afaik.

Comment: I've figured out what your code is doing, each time it goes around the loop, the `1` is messing up your logic. The values being printed out are: 1, 12, 132, 1442, 15742 ...

Comment: +1 for "I still don't get it"

Comment: I was revisiting a bunch of these, and I realised that I never explained what was happening. Oops :P Anyway, your code does: `F_n = (10 * F_n-1 + 1) + (10 * F_n-2 + 1)`.

Comment: Very interesting. In general Hexagony has been one of my favorite programming languages posted on PPCG. I have never used it myself, but it's a very original language. I would love to see a few more snippets since you are currently at length 8 & upvotes 20.

Answer (score 20):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal)

**Note:** All snippets will be shown as if they were entered into a clean REPL.

#### 39 bytes

```
Charcoal> ＵＯＮＮO_¶_OＡＫＡαＡ№αOβＨＷψβ«Ａ§α§⌕ＡαO‽βXＡ№αOβ
```

This is an animated example, so REPL output is not shown. It's also the [submission for Make a Bubble-wrap simulator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113031/39244). It uses the `AssignAtIndex` (`Ａ§`) command, which, when used with the `Cells` datatype (obtainable from `Peek` commands), changes the canvas.

#### 30 bytes

```
Charcoal> ×⁶()↙↓¹⁰↖↖¹⁰↓↓²↘⁸Ｍ↑__↖←¤:↗¤≕Pi
()()()()()()
|\3.1415926|
|:\53589793|
\::\2384626|
 \::\433832|
  \::\79502|
   \::\8841|
    \::\971|
     \::\69|
      \::\3|
       \__\|
```

This is the (noncompeting) [submission for Bake a Slice of Pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112396/39244). It shows the (very unfinished) Wolfram Language support.

#### 11 bytes

```
Charcoal> Ｇ↘↗↘↗↖↙↖↙⁵#  
    #       #    
   ###     ###   
  #####   #####  
 ####### ####### 
#################
 ####### ####### 
  #####   #####  
   ###     ###   
    #       #
```

`Polygon(:DownRight, :UpRight, :DownRight, :UpRight, :UpLeft, :DownLeft, :UpLeft, :DownLeft, 5, '#')`. An example of a more complex polygon.

#### 10 bytes

```
Charcoal> Ｇ↗↘←⁴*#Ｍ↓*
   #   
  *#*  
 #*#*# 
*#*#*#*
   *
```

`Polygon(:UpRight, :DownRight, :Left, 4, '*#'); Move(:Down); Print('*')`. An example of multi-character fill in `Polygon`.

#### 9 bytes

```
Charcoal> ┌┐‖Ｍ↓
┌┐
└┘
```

`Print('┌┐');ReflectMirror(:Down)`. Another ASCII-art oriented builtin. Note that `┌` and `┐` count as three bytes each.

#### 8 bytes

```
Charcoal> Ｐ+abcＵＢ*
**c**
**b**
cbabc
**b**
**c**
```

`Multiprint(:+, 'abc');SetBackground('*')`. A very useful builtin in many situations.

#### 7 bytes

```
Charcoal> Ｂ⁵¦⁵123
12312
1   3
3   1
2   2
13213
```

`Box(5, 5, '123')`. Demonstrates one of the many builtins with overloads for strings of length greater than 1.

#### 6 bytes

```
Charcoal> aＪ³¦³a
a    


    a
```

This isn't a very interesting one - `Print('a');Jump(3, 3);Print('a');` but it demonstrates the separator `¦`, useful when you have two numbers or two strings in a row.

#### 5 bytes

```
Charcoal> Ｇ↗↘⁴_
   _   
  ___  
 _____ 
_______
```

An alternate syntax for `Polygon` - `Polygon(:UpRight, :DownRight, 4, '_')`, also demonstrating its autofill feature, when the cursor does not end up in the starting position.

#### 4 bytes

```
Charcoal> Ｇ+⁵a
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
```

In verbose mode, this is `Polygon(:+, 5, 'a')`. Self-explanatory. Any identifier with a preceding `:` is attempted to be parsed as a direction.

#### 3 bytes

```
Charcoal> ＷＳι
Enter string: a
Enter string: sdf
Enter string: 

asdf
```

This is a while loop. In verbose mode this is equivalent to:

```
While(InputString()) {
    Print(i)
}
```

Loop variables are automatically chosen as the first free variable (greek letter starting at iota and wrapping around after omega). Truthiness is the same as Python truthiness.

#### 2 bytes

```
Charcoal> ‽⁵
---
```

This demonstrates the syntax for operators, in this case a monadic `Random` operator. The syntax for integers can also be seen here, which is just a run of superscript digits. This returns an integer, which is implicitly printed as a line of that length using a character in `\/-|` depending on the direction of the line. In verbose mode this is `Random(5)`.

#### 1 byte

```
Charcoal> a
a
```

Expressions are implicitly printed if they are not preceded by a command character.

#### Factoid:

This language was designed specifically for ASCII-art challenges. The 95 printable ASCII characters aren't used as commands, so string literals are not delimited.

Answer (score 19):

## Z80 Machine Code

#### Factoid

The Z80 is probably the most famous CPU developed by Zilog. The company Zilog was started by dissatisfied Intel employees and their first CPU, the aforementioned Z80, was fully compatible with Intel's 8080, as well as having its own set of extended instructions. This was a big selling point as it meant that CP/M (a very popular OS in its day, designed for the 8080) could be run on a computer using a Z80 CPU with no changes to the software.

#### Length 1 snippet:

```
HEX Op code   Instruction name
-----------   ----------------
AF            XOR  A
```

Being an 8-bit processor, the Z80 has many 1-byte instructions of varying usefulness. On the surface this instruction would not seem to be particularly useful as what it does is calculate `A` XOR `A`, storing the result in `A`. However, since the result is always 0 and all other ways of setting `A` (the Z80's main register or **A**ccumulator) to 0 are longer than 1 byte, that makes this an interesting and useful instruction! It also has the side effects of setting the `Z` **Z**ero flag (to 1) and resetting the `C` **C**arry flag (to 0). If you don't mind losing the previous value in `A` this is also a shorter way of resetting `C`, although there are other non-destructive ways of resetting `C` in one byte. The more obvious way takes two bytes.

#### Length 2 snippet:

```
HEX Op code   Instruction name
-----------   ----------------
10 nn         DJNZ n
```

This is a combination instruction. Its full name is **D**ecrement **J**ump **N**on **Z**ero. It combines Decrement B (`DEC B`) with Jump Relative Non Zero (`JR NZ, n`) for a saving of one byte (very important for code golf!) It is also 3 T-states faster than using the two instructions separately, the actual time taken being dependant on the CPU's speed, typically 4 MHz. There is no other register that can be used instead of B and the only test for the jump is NZ, making this instruction unique because most other instructions have "siblings" such as the 75 different 8-bit load (`LD`) instructions.

If the value stored in B (an 8-bit register) is zero after being decremented, the program jumps n bytes, where n is a signed 8-bit integer. This means n can be anywhere from -128 to 127. The closest analogy with higher languages is the FOR loop where the code is executed B times. If B already contains 0 the first time DJNZ is executed, B gets decremented to 0xFF (-1 / +255) resulting in the loop executing another 255 times.

The simplest form is `10 FE    # DJNZ -2` which jumps back two bytes (to itself) until B is zero. All this would do is make sure B is zero and delay the execution of the following code by an amount proportional to the initial value of B. Alternatively, the offset could be a positive amount, skipping the subsequent code the first B times. Interestingly, this instruction affects no flags, not even the Zero flag so extra size/time savings and/or more straightforward code can be obtained if it is wanted to pass the current value of Z to another part of the program.

#### Length 3 snippet:

```
HEX Op code   Instruction name
-----------   ----------------
DD 77 nn      LD   (IX+n), A
```

This introduces one of the two 16-bit index registers: IX. IX and its sister register, IY, are used to address offsets from memory locations without having to change the value of the register. A one byte, signed offset is set in the code (`nn` in the HEX code above). This is useful if you are reading or writing several non-continuous bytes from a single offset or multiple offsets in sequence. What this particular instruction does is **L**oa**D** the 8-bit value at the memory address (IX+n) with the value in the A register.

All instructions that use the IX register are prefixed with `DD`. This actually just changes the following instruction to use IX instead of HL, and then reads an additional byte after the Op code if it is in indirect addressing mode (indicated by the use of parentheses in the instruction name). The instruction `77       # LD   (HL), A` is the same instruction, but using HL instead of an indexing register.

IX is always intended to be used as a 16-bit index register, however, there are several unofficial, undocumented codes that allow using it as two 8-bits registers, HX and HL, just like the regular 8-bit registers H and L.

#### Length 4 snippet:

```
HEX Op code   Instruction name
-----------   ----------------
FD 36 nn xx   LD   (IY+n), x
```

There are very few 4-byte single instructions, all of which are similar in function and use one of the two index registers. This time I am using IY. All IY instructions are prefixed with `FD`. It is almost identical to the previous example but using a direct value instead of a register. It **L**oa**D**s the 8-bit value at the memory address (IY+n) with the value `x` in the last byte of the instruction. (Normally, this op-code would be written `LD   (IY+d), n` but I am avoiding using `d` to prevent confusion with the hex digit `D`.)

Because of the way that `DD` and `FD` work, you can actually chain any number of `DD` and `FD` bytes together. Only the last one will take effect, wasting both memory and clock cycles. For example, `FD FD DD AF` will set the current instruction to use IY instead of HL, then IY again, then IX, then ignore them all and execute `XOR A` (see the length 1 snippet). As you can see, although it produces valid code, it is only useful to prefix instructions with `DD` or `FD` if they normally use the HL register (or the H or L registers if you are using undocumented instructions). The CPU automatically resets to using the HL register instead of an index register after each instruction, whether or not an index register actually ended up getting used.

#### Length 5 snippet:

```
HEX Op code   Instruction name
-----------   ----------------
AF            XOR  A
80            ADD  A, B
05            DEC  B
20 FC         JR   NZ, -4
```

There are no single instructions longer than 4 bytes (except for the aforementioned wasteful instructions) so now I need to write mini programs! This snippet calculates the *n*th triangular number (mod 256 since these registers are 8-bit) from 1 to 256. On entry the B register contains *n*. On exit the A register contains the result, B contains 0, the Z flag is set, the other flags are corrupted (not guaranteed to stay unchanged, nor to hold useful values, although the value of each flag will be the same after every time this snippet is run; the values are not random and can be predetermined) and all other registers are preserved (unchanged). How can it calculate 256 since the largest 8-bit unsigned value is 255 and why doesn't it calculate 0?

It sets the A register to 0 (see the length 1 snippet), **ADD**s B to A, storing the result in A then **DEC**rements B. If the value of B is 0 *after* being decremented, then the Z flag is set. The last instruction **J**umps **R**elative to the current position if the Z flag is not set (**N**on-**Z**ero), i.e. if B is not 0. `FC` is treated as a signed value, so it jumps by -4 bytes from the end of the `JR   NZ, n` instruction if the condition is met. So, if B is already 0 upon entry, decrementing it will overflow and set it to 255, causing the snippet to loop 256 times. The largest value it can calculate without overflowing is *Tri*(22)=253. The result of the next value, *Tri*(23) is 20 because 276 doesn't fit in an 8-bit number.

Comment: I just started page 4 of this question!

Comment: if it is compatible to the 8080, how is the Z80 machine code different from 8080 machine code?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann The Z80 extends four unused op-codes. All 8080 op-codes are single byte but the Z80 has multi-byte op-codes starting with `CB`, `DD`, `ED` & `FD`. A lot of these are used to address registers that don't exist in the 8080.

Answer (score 19):

### TeX

TeX was the first language to get its own StackExchange site.

(Note that we will show examples in plain TeX mostly; if any example is to be compiled using LaTeX, it will be clearly stated.)

### 10 `cuff\/link`

TeX works well with  [ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) such as `ff`, `fl`, `ffl` or `fi` by default, i.e., it takes the correct ligature glyph from the font automatically. This is in general welcome of course, however, in some cases, it is frowned upon, such as in compound words. Compare the following two renderings of the word *cufflink*, the first one proper (ligature broken on the compound word boundary) and the second one improper (ligature crossing the compound word boundary). The first one is achieved by adding `\/` in the code in the correct place.

[image]

### 9 `\badness0`

Yes, in TeX, you can define how "bad" things are :-) Well, actually, badness inserted in a paragraph of text says how bad it is if a linebreak appeared at the specific place. Some things insert their own badnesses; for instance, it is worse to hyphenate words than not to, and the non-breaking space has badness of 10000, which is, in a sense, the infinite badness in TeX's eyes. Here, we set the badness to zero. We also see that assignments in plain TeX are done by concatenating the register (`\badness` here) and the value; optionally we can place the equals sign in between.

Actually, the concept of penalties (badnesses) is crucial for TeX; it's a typographic system and beauty is one of the goals, and Knuth designed TeX so that only deterministic algorithms are used to break paragraphs into lines and lines into pages, to ensure at least reasonable stability.

### 8 `\def\x{}`

Simple definition. This defines a macro ("control sequence" in proper words) which does not take an argument and expands to ... well ... nothing :) (Do not be confused: "nothing" is not "relax", they substantially different.)

### 7 `$$a+b$$` or `\[a+b\]`

Two snippets that *somehow* produce the same output, it's a displayed equation showing simple

> *a* + *b*

(just centred of course). The first is the correct thing to do in plain TeX. If only people knew how wrong it is in LaTeX, where the second one should be used!

### 6 `\relax`

TeX is one of the languages that have its own "do nothing" action. However, `\relax` is more than just that, and this is related to the fact that it is an *expansion language*: All macros are expanded, and in some contexts, executed. The power of `\relax` is that it is executed to nothing, but it cannot be expanded, i.e., it survives any expansion unmodified. This in turn is one of the strenghts (and threats at the same time, especially for newcomers) of TeX.

### 5 `X\bye`

A minimal document that compiles producing an output; we get a page with a 10-point "X" at the top and a centred page number "1" at the bottom. *... "X," said Tom, and added, leaving: "Bye!"*

### 4 `\bye`

When you say "bye" to TeX, it finishes the document; namely it closes the current paragraph if any is open, ships out the last page, and ends. Without this command, no document can be successfully produced.

### 3 `$a$`

Prints the mathematical symbol "a", that can stand for instance for a variable, function or a constant. Without the dollars, it would be the text symbol "a"; it is necessary to distinguish these two!

### 2 `<endline><endline>`

Two consecutive ends of line finish a paragraph. (One end of line behaves like a space.)

### 1 `%`

The percent sign starts a comment; the comment runs until the end of line, and eats the end of line together with leading whitespace on the next line.

Comment: You have 6 more facts to add... :)

Answer (score 19):

### [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/tree/v1)/[Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously)

**Length 16 snippet**

```
????????????????
```

Like the length 10 snippet originally was, this snippet is hidden until somebody finds the easter egg.

In [this commit](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/commit/ae71a1bb9a3663713ae479421f1595f246ba02b6), I introduced an easter egg. If you input the correct 16-byte code as an Actually program, something special will happen!

**Length 15 snippet**

```
[1,2,3,4,5];♀ⁿσ
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=WzEsMiwzLDQsNV074pmA4oG_z4M&input=)

This snippet showcases two new features of Actually:

- The binary map operator `♀`: it works like `♂`, but maps a binary function over the top two stack elements, instead of mapping a unary function over the top element.
- The cumulative sum function `σ`: it takes a list as input, and outputs a list where each element is the sum of the first `n` elements of the input list.

The program outputs the cumulative sums of `[x**x for x in [1,2,3,4,5]]`. The equivalent Python code would be `[1**1,1**1+2**2,1**1+2**2+3**3,1**1+2**2+3**3+4**4,1**1+2**2+3**3+4**4+5**5]`.

**Length 14 snippet**

```
1WX╚;;S=YWX♂.X
```

This snippet sorts the input list using bogosort and prints out each value in ascending order, separated by newlines.

Cool things in this snippet:

- Implicit input: because there are no input commands (`,`, `○`, `♀`, or `╩`) in the code, Actually reads all input, parses it, and pushes it before beginning evaluation of the code.
- The `♂` command: it's a shortcut for the map (`M`) command. It takes the next command (`.` in the above snippet) and maps it over the list on top of the stack. `♂.` is functionally equivalent to the following (and 2 bytes shorter!):

```
`.`M
```

**Length 13 snippet**

```
:12345678;;+▼
```

This snippet shows off a lot of new things. In no particular order:

- `:12345678`: improved numeric parsing. Rather than needing to be wrapped in `:`s, numerics merely need to be prefixed with one, and are parsed as the longest string following the `:` consisting only of characters in `0123456789+-.ij`.
- `▼`: new function (gcd reduce). In this form, it pops two integer values off the top of the stack, and pushes them divided by their gcd.
- `▼`: dingbats for characters `0x01 - 0x1F`. No more typing those pesky invisible or formatting-ruining ASCII control codes.

**Length 12 snippet**

```
[[1,2],[3,4]
```

Now that [Seriously v2.0 (codename Actually)](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/releases/tag/v2.0) has been released, it's time to start showing off some nifty features I've added. This snippet shows off nested lists - something that Seriously was lacking because I didn't take the time to write a good parser when I created it. This pushes `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` to the stack.

But wait, it's missing the ending bracket! *Actually*, it isn't. It's implied at EOF. However, the inner list(s) still need their ending brackets, even if the ending brackets are at the end of the source code. This may be changed soon.

**Length 11 snippet**

**Note: this is defunct as of now, due to the Heroku site being disabled. No worries though, a similar easter egg will be added into the actual Python interpreter soon.**

```
↑↑↓↓←→←→ba
```

A newline at the end makes this 11. This is the infamous [Konami code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code) - "up up down down left right left right b a" (pressing enter to confirm the code, like start in Contra). Entering this in the [online interpreter](https://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com), using the arrow keys for the directional inputs, will result in a fun little easter egg - the second easter egg I added.

**Length 10 snippet**

```
??????????
```

I added two easter eggs to the Seriously interpreter recently. The first one (from [this commit](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/commit/fb4170c5023975520b346103dec7f10b79070f8d)) involves doing something special when your code starts with a certain 10 characters. <s>However, I don't want to spoil the secret, so until somebody figures it out, the above code will just be 10 question marks (which is *not* the secret).</s>

Since I've [revealed the original secret](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31129955#31129955) in chat, I might as well reveal it here too.

> In v1, back before I removed the easter egg, if your code started with `^^vv<><>ba`, the rest of the code would get `exec`'d (run as Python code).

The `?` character will eventually be used as a prefix for some two-byte commands, once the single-byte command table fills up. In addition, once I get it working, `??` will be a comment delimiter.

*Update: This secret was causing the interpreter to misbehave, so it has been removed for now. It will come back later, once I can make sure it doesn't break things again.*

**Length 7 snippet**

```
,▓r`P`M
```

This snippet prints a list of the primes that are less than or equal to the input value.

```
 ,    push input (indented one extra space here so that the below character doesn't hide it)
▓    pop a: push pi(a) (# of primes less than or equal to a)
r    pop a: push range(0, a) ([0,...,a-1])
`P`  define a function that executes P (pop a: push the ath zero-indexed prime)
M    pop a function f and a list l, apply f to each element of l
```

Seriously is *seriously* powerful and terse when it comes to math. I refuse to apologize for the terrible pun.

**Length 6 snippet**

`╦ï*╠^φ`

This snippet showcases the mathematical constant builtins:

`╦` pushes `π`.

`ï` pushes `i`, the imaginary unit.

`*` multiplies the top two values.

`╠` pushes `e`.

`^` pops `a` and `b`, and pushes `pow(a,b)`.

`φ` pushes `φ`, the golden ratio.

Output:

```
1.61803398875
(-1+1.22464679915e-16j)
```

This snippet demonstrates Euler's Identity, one of the most important identities in complex analysis: `e^(i*π) = -1`. The output value isn't quite `-1` due to floating-point precision issues and rounding errors, but it's very close. It also outputs `φ` because I needed a 6th character and I wanted to show off all of the math constants.

**Length 5 snippet**

`:1+2j`

Complex number support! I worked a long time on getting this functioning, because Python 2 (the language Seriously is implemented in) does annoying things involving complex numbers.

`:` is the numeric delimiter - everything between it and the next `:` (or, in this case, EOF - hooray, more implied delimiters) is interpreted as a numeric value and pushed. If it can't be interpreted as a numeric value, `0` is pushed instead, following the tenet of No Errors.

**Length 4 snippet**

`asdf`

`a`: invert the stack

`s`: pop `a`: push `sgn(a)`

`d`: pop `[a]`: dequeue a value `b` from `[a]`, push `[a],b`

`f`: pop `a`: push the index of `a` in the Fibonacci sequence, or `-1` if `a` is not a Fibonacci number.

Pretty simple, right? Wait... There's nothing on the stack! How is this program supposed to work?

In Seriously, one of the fundamental design tenets was that there are no errors. If a command does not get an appropriate value from the stack, it does not throw an error. Instead, it restores the stack and quietly exits. All of these commands are NOPs when the stack is empty.

**Length 3 snippet**

`,,+`

This reads in 2 values and adds them (for whatever adding means for the two values). If you pass in two ints, like `5` and `3`, the result will be `8`. If you input two strings like `"foo"` and `"bar"`, they are concatenated to form `"barfoo"` (reversed because they are appended in the order they appear on the stack). If you input two lists, the result will be appending the second to the first: `[1,2,3][3,4,5]+ -> [3,4,5,1,2,3]`. Adding functions results in their code being appended. Whatever the result, it will be printed to STDOUT.

...wait, why is it printed to STDOUT? There's no `.` in that snippet! Or is there? When a Seriously program terminates, each value on the stack is popped and printed - there's no need for an explicit `.` or `ü` at the end of a program. This is just another feature that saves those ever-precious bytes.

**Length 2 snippet**

`1W`

This is an infinite loop. `1` pushes the integer 1 onto the stack, and `W` is a loop delimiter - the code inside the loop (which is nothing) executes while the value on top of the stack (which is peeked, not popped) is a truthy value (not `0`, `''`, `[]`, or an empty function). This snippet shows off one of my favorite features in Seriously: like TI-BASIC, closing delimiters are not needed at the end of programs; they are implicitly present at EOF.

**Length 1 snippet**

`H`

This prints `Hello, World!` to STDOUT if the stack is empty.

**Factoid**

Seriously got its name from [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58522/seriously-golfscript-cjam-or-pyth).

Comment: Is the secret easter egg code: `Seriously?`? Just a random guess.

Comment: @DJgamer98 Try it and find out :)

Comment: -1 interpreter doesnt exist

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Oh yeah I need to add the Easter egg into the language proper since I killed off the heroku app. Watch this space for more stuff once I finish the first release of v2.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy What do you mean an interpreter doesn't exist? http://seriously.tryitonline.net/

Comment: @mbomb007 I mean the old Heroku online interpreter is dead.

Answer (score 19):

## [beeswax](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beeswax)

**Factoid**:

beeswax is a self-modifying 2D esoteric programming language created by Manuel Lohmann, based on a 2-dimensional hexagonal grid. Every cell in a beeswax program (the honeycomb) has 6 neighbors.

```
  2 — 1
 / \ / \
3 — β — 0
 \ / \ /
  4 — 5
```

Actual layout:

```
21
3β0
 45
```

Instruction pointers (called bees) travel around on the honeycomb. Bees can pick up values from any location on the honeycomb, or drop values on it, potentially changing its size and content. Every bee carries a stack (local stack/lstack), with a fixed length of 3. Bees can interact with a global stack (gstack) of unlimited length that’s accessible by all bees. The gstack only allows basic stack operations like rotating up, down (similar to how Piet handles the stack) and pushing and popping values on or off the stack. All arithmetic or bitwise manipulation of data has to be done by bees.
All values in beeswax are unsigned 64-bit integers.

[GitHub repository to a beeswax interpreter written in Julia](https://github.com/m-lohmann/BeeswaxEsolang.jl)

---

All snippets in reverse order:

**Length 15 snippet** (introducing the print toggle switch)

The good old plain “Hello, World!”

```
*`Hello, World!
```

The backtick character `` ` `` is a toggle switch to print every character encountered after the switch to STDOUT until a second backtick toggles the output off again or until the bee leaves the honeycomb or the program ends, whichever occurs first.

**Length 14 snippet**

in the works

**Length 13 snippet**

in the works

**Length 12 snippet II**

```
p{N<P{*
>~+d
```

Another 12 bytes long example. This calculates and outputs the fibonacci sequence, part of my solution to the [Fibonacci function or sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67683/39407) challenge.

Finally a program doing something more useful again.

Explanation:

```
          lstack     output
      *   [0 0 0]•            create bee
     {                 0      output lstack 1st as integer to STDOUT
    P     [0 0 1]•            increment lstack 1st
   <                      (1) redirect to left
  N                   \n      output newline to STDOUT
 {                     1      output lstack 1st as integer to STDOUT
p                             redirect to lower left
>~        [0 1 0]•            redirect to right, flip lstack 1st and 2nd
  +d      [0 1 1]•            lstack 1st=1st+2nd, redirect to upper right
   <                          redirect to left, loop back to (1)
  N                   \n      utput newline to STDOUT
 {                     1
p
>~        [0 1 1]•
  +d      [0 1 2]•
   <
  N                   \n
 {                     2
p
>~+d      [0 2 3]•
  N<                  \n
p{                     3
>~+d      [0 3 5]•
  N<                  \n
p{                     5
...
...
```

This outputs the fibonacci sequence, but only up to the 93rd element, after which 64bit-wraparound causes the sequence to produce wrong values:

```
       ...
4660046610375530309
7540113804746346429
12200160415121876738   ← 93rd Fibonacci number, last correct value
1293530146158671551    ← 1st. case of 64-bit overflow/wraparound
13493690561280548289
       ...
```

Implementing a longer word length is possible, of course. Maybe I can implement such a fibonacci sequence program in one of the next examples.

**Length 12 snippet**

This is my contribution to the [Code that executes only once challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76415/39407).
You have to save this program in a file named `!`.
This program does not add any new fancy ideas—it is just a slightly modified realization of the idea shown in snippet length 10.

```
_8F+++P]f1Fw
```

Explanation

```
                  lstack                        gstack
_8F+++P        [0x08,0x08,0x21]•
       ]       [0x08,0x08,0x2100000000000000]•                        rotate bits of lstack 1st by lstack 2nd steps to the right
        f1     [0x08,0x08,0x01]•               [0x2100000000000000]•  push lstack 1st on gstack, set lstack 1st to 1
          Fw   [0x01,0x01,0x01]•                                      write file named "!" (Char(0x21)) with content 0x00 (1 byte).
```

So, during execution the program overwrites its own file, so it can’t be executed again.

**Length 11 snippet** (clear screen using ANSI escape sequence)

```
_3F..}`[2J`
```

This is my beeswax example for the task *Terminal control—Clear the sreen* on rosettacode, which can be found [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Clear_the_screen#beeswax).

```
• marks top of stack
             lstack
_            [0 0 0]•    create bee
 3           [0 0 3]•    lstack 1st=1
  F          [3 3 3]•    all lstack = 1st
   .         [3 3 9]•    1st=1st*2nd
    .        [3 3 27]•   1st=1st*2nd
     }                   output lstack 1st as char to STDOUT
      `[2J`              output `[2J` to STDOUT
```

This program uses the ANSI escape sequence `ESC[2J`, as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Examples).
`27` is the ASCII code for the control character `ESC`, `[2J` is the rest of the ANSI escape sequence to clear the screen.

**Length 10 snippet** (introducing the file write instruction)

```
_Z~8~]f1Fw
```

This program writes a file named “Z”, containing one byte of information: `0`

```
             lstack               gstack
_           [0,0,0]•                                 create bee
 Z          [0,0,90]•                                pick up value from relative address lstack(1st,2nd), see length 7 snippet.
  ~         [0,90,0]•                                flip lstack 1st,2nd
   8        [0,90,8]•                                lstack 1st=8
    ~       [0,8,90]•                                flip lstack 1st,2nd
     ]      [0,8,6485183463413514240]•               rotate bits of lstack 1st by lstack 2nd steps to the right.
      f     [0,8,6485..4240]• [6485183463413514240]• push lstack 1st on gstack
       1    [0,8,1]•                                 lstack 1st=1
        F   [1,1,1]•                                 set all lstack to 1st value
         w                                           write file [-,filebytes,namebytes]•
```

The “magic” becomes obvious if we look at the hex values of the stack contents:

```
                                   lstack                                     gstack

_           [0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000]•
 Z          [0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000,0x000000000000005a]•
  ~         [0x0000000000000000,0x000000000000005a,0x0000000000000000]•
   8        [0x0000000000000000,0x000000000000005a,0x0000000000000008]•
    ~       [0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000008,0x000000000000005a]•
     ]      [0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000008,0x5a00000000000000]•
      f     [0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000008,0x5a00000000000000]• [0x5a00000000000000]•
       1    [0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000008,0x0000000000000001]•
        F   [0x0000000000000001,0x0000000000000001,0x0000000000000001]•                                 
         w
```

At instruction `w` lstack is `[1,1,1]•`. This means, lstack 1st bytes (1 byte) of gstack are used for the file name, and lstack 2nd bytes (1 byte) are used for the file content. The first byte of gstack is `0x5a`, or `90` in decimal. This is the ASCII code for the character `Z`. The next byte is `0x00`,which is the file content.
So, this program creates a file `Z` with the content `0x00`.

**Length 9 snippet**
in the works...

**Length 8 snippet II** (truth machine, introducing all conditional operators)

My solution to the challenge [Implement a Truth Machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68730/39407). My full explanation can be found there.

```
 _T> "{'j
```

It’s not a real showcase without a truth machine, right? ;)
This example also showcases two different conditional jump instructions that are working hand in hand in their functionality.

If lstack is `[0,0,0]•` (the user entered `0`) then the bee only visits the instructions:

```
_T> "{'
```

and jumps outside the honeycomb, which terminates the program after printing out one `0` to STDOUT.

If lstack is `[0,0,1]•` (the user enters `1`) then the case gets more interesting:

```
_T> " 'j'{"> " 'j'{"> " 'j'{">....
```

which lets the program output an infinite stream of `1`s to STDOUT.
Instruction `j` reflects the direction of the IP horizontally (see the list at the length 4 snippet) to run the check over and over again.

Beeswax has 4 conditional and one unconditional “skip next” instructions:

`'`  skip next instruction if `lstack 1st value = 0`.

`"`  skip next instruction if `lstack 1st value > 0`.

`K`  skip next instruction if `lstack 1st value = 2nd value`.

`L`  skip next instruction if `lstack 1st value > 2nd value`.

`Q`  skip next instruction unconditionally.

**Length 8 snippet** (introducing absolute addressing)

```
_4F(@0@D
```

Explanation:

```
          lstack
_         [0,0,0]•        create bee
 4        [0,0,4]•        lstack 1st=4
  F       [4,4,4]•        lstack=lstack 1st
   (      [4,4,64]•       1st=1st<<2nd (arithmetic shift left)
    @     [64,4,4]•       flip lstack 1st/3rd
     0    [64,4,0]•       lstack 1st=0
      @   [0,4,64]•       flip back
       D                  drop lstack 1st at row,column = lstack 2nd,3rd
```

Result:

```
 _4F(@0@D


@
```

The 3 instructions `D`(drop value at cell), `G`(get value from cell) and `J`(jump to cell) use absolute addressing. Beeswax programs use 1-indexed coordinates, the y coordinate pointing “downwards”, with the origin at the upper left corner of the honeycomb.
Instruction `D` has the ability to change the size of the honeycomb by dropping values outside the current honeycomb area. Growth in positive direction (down and right) is only limited by the `UInt64` number range, growth in negative direction is only possible if values get dropped to the coordinate `(0,n)`, `(n,0)` or `(0,0)`.
The example above drops the value `64` (ASCII for `@`) at `(row,column)=(4,0)`
Column `0` is the (imaginary) column right at the left border of the honeycomb. If the honeycomb grows in negative direction, then the origin of the new honeycomb gets reset to the new upper left corner. That means, in the example above, the new origin `(1,1)` changes to the coordinate left of the `_`. Negative growth is only possible in steps of 1 because unlike the relative addressing instructions, `D` does not recognize 2’s complements as negative numbers.

A little word of advice: Don’t try to drop values at too high addresses because you’ll run out of memory very quickly. An area of roughly 11,600x11,600 cells already needs at least 1 GB of memory (if the cells only contain 8-bit values and no multibyte characters).

**length 7 snippet** (introducing relative addressing)

```
_T";@Z}
```

The program above is not really useful, but it demonstrates how the code manipulation instructions that address cells locally work in beeswax.
There are two of these instructions that address cells locally: `Y` and `Z`.
Instruction `Y` drops values to a cell that’s addressed relative to the position of `Y` in the program.
Instruction `Z` picks up a value from a cell that’s addressed relative to the position of the `Z` instruction. As all values in beeswax are unsigned 64 bit integers, there is a problem. You can’t address any cells at relative addresses lower than `(row,column)=(0,0)`. But bees aren’t stupid, so they figured out how to solve that problem by using the two’s complement of the addresses for the cells in question, meaning cells located at the left or below (the coordinate system of the honeycomb is flipped upside down). The two’s complement of a 64 bit integer `n` is simply `2^64-n`.

The addressing works identical for instruction `Y`.

At instruction `Z` in the example, relative address

`(0,0)` is the cell of the instruction itself, returning the value 90, the ASCII value of `Z`.

`(0,1)` returns 125, the ASCII value of  `}`

`(0,2)` returns 0, the default return value if the relative address is outside the honeycomb.

`(0,-1)` becomes `(0,18446744073709551615)` and returns `64`, the ASCII value for `@`, and so on.

Z picks up values at the relative address `lstack[column,row,-]•` and puts the value that’s found at that address on top of the lstack.

Program flow:

```
_                            create bee
 T                           read in integer from STDIN (enter column of character to be read)
  "                          skip next instruction if lstack 1st>0
   ;                         terminate program (if user entered 0)
    @                        flip lstack 1st and 3rd values
     Z                       pick up value from cell at lstack[column,row,-]3
      }                      output lstack 1st as char to STDOUT
```

Examples:

```
julia> beeswax("snippet7.bswx")
i0

Program finished!

julia> beeswax("snippet7.bswx")
i1
}
Program finished!

julia> beeswax("snippet7.bswx")
i2
�
Program finished!

julia> beeswax("snippet7.bswx")
i18446744073709551615
@
Program finished!

julia> beeswax("snippet7.bswx")
i18446744073709551614
;
Program finished!

julia> beeswax("snippet7.bswx")
i18446744073709551613
"
Program finished!
```

**Length 6 snippet**
(Introducing lstack I/O)

```
*T~T+{
```

Introducing new instructions: `T` and `~`

Explanation:
(`•` marks top of stack)

```
        lstack

*T      [0,0,a]•     Create bee. Get integer from STDIN, store as lstack 1st value.
  ~     [0,a,0]•     Flip lstack 1st and 2nd values.
   T    [0,a,b]•     Get integer from STDIN, store as lstack 1st value.
    +   [0,a,a+b]•   lstack 1st = lstack 1st + lstack 2nd.
     {  [0,a,a+b]•   Output lstack 1st to STDOUT
```

This program adds two positive integers given by the user.

There are 4 I/O operators that interact only with the lstack:

`T` Get integer value from STDIN, store as lstack top value.

`,` Get character from STDIN, store its value as lstack top value.

`{` Output lstack top value as integer to STDOUT.

`}` Output lstack top value as Character to STDOUT.

Just for convenience, during program execution `T` and `,` give different output for the input request, so the user knows what is wanted by the program.

`T` outputs an `i` to remind the user that an integer is requested.
`,` outputs a `c` to remind the user that a character is requested.

The program above looks like this during execution:

```
julia> beeswax("A+B.bswx")
i3
i5
8
Program finished!
```

**Length 5 snippet**

```
_9FB{
```

This program ouputs `387420489` to STDOUT, which is the result of `9^9`.

Explanation (`•` marks top of stack):

```
step          lstack

_9          [0,0,9]•         Create bee, set lstack top value to 9.
  F         [9,9,9]•         Set all lstack values to the first value. 
   B        [9,9,387420489]• lstack top = top^2nd.
    {       [9,9,387420489]• output lstack top to STDOUT.
```

In beeswax, the numbers `0...9` set the top of lstack to the appropriate integer value.

`F` sets all lstack values equal to the topmost value.
The other operator setting all lstack values to the same value is `z` (not used here), which sets all lstack values to `0`.

This is the first example that uses an arithmetic operator, `B`, which raises lstack 1st to the power of lstack 2nd value.

**Length 4 snippet**
(Introducing redirection and reflection instructions)

```
>_{j
```

This program outputs an infinite string of zeros.

```
time      state  output

tick 0:    >_{j
tick 1:    >α{j         _ creates two bees:
                        the first (α) moving right.
                        the second (β) moving left.
tick 2:    β_αj    0    α executes { and outputs its topmost lstack value to STDOUT.
                        β gets redirected to move to the right.
tick 3:    >β{α         α arrives at j, gets mirrored back to the left.
                        β moves to the right, ignoring the _ instruction.
tick 4:    >_αj    00   α and β arrive at the { instruction,
                        both output their top lstack value to SDTOUT, first α, then β.
tick 5:    >α{β         α moves on, β gets reflected.
tick 6:    α_βj    0    α gets redirected to the right
                        β outputs top lstack value to STDOUT.
tick 7:    >α{j         α and β arrive at _ and move on.
                        This state is identical to the state at tick 1.
tick 8:    β_αj    0    Identical to state at tick 2.
  .          .     .                   .
  .          .     .                   .
  .          .     .                   .
```

beeswax has 6 **direct redirection** instructions: `< b d > q p`, redirecting to the left, upper left, upper right, right, lower right and lower left, respectively, as shown in the diagram below (α showing the bee, the numbers the direction):

```
  b   d
   2 1 
< 3 α 0 >
   4 5 
  p   q
```

**Indirect redirections**

Here is a table with all mirroring instructions and their resulting reflected direction.

`a` and `x` turn the direction one step clockwise and counterclockwise.

`O` reflects all directions in the opposite direction.

`s`,`t`,`u` reflect along the main axes `\`(2-5),`/`(1-4),`—`(0-3).

`j`,`k`,`l` reflect along the half axes `|`(between 1-4 and 2-5),`/`(between 0-3 and 1-4),`\`(between 0-3 and 2-5).

```
╔════════════════════════════════════╗
║incoming  a  x  s  t  u  j  k  l  O ║
╠════════════════════════════════════╣
║   0      1  5  4  2  0  3  1  5  3 ║
║   1      2  0  3  1  5  2  0  4  2 ║
║   2      3  1  2  0  4  1  5  3  1 ║
║   3      4  2  1  5  3  0  4  2  0 ║
║   4      5  3  0  4  2  5  3  1  5 ║
║   5      0  4  5  3  1  4  2  0  4 ║
╚════════════════════════════════════╝
```

**Length 3 snippet**

Cat program.

```
_,}
```

Introducing two new instructions:

`,` reads a character from STDIN and pushes its value on top of lstack.

`}` returns lstack top value as character to STDOUT.

**Length 2 snippet**

```
*{
```

Introducing the `{` instruction, which outputs the integer value of the top of the lstack to STDOUT. The lstacks of all created IPs/bees are initialized to `[0,0,0]` at program start, so this program just ouputs `0` to STDOUT.

**Length 1 snippet**

The shortest valid beeswax program contains at least 1 of 4 instructions to create bees at the start of the program.

A program only containing one of these instructions does not accomplish anything; the bees get destroyed as soon as they leave the honeycomb. A program that loses all its bees during runtime gets automatically terminated.

- `*` creates 6 bees, each moving in one of the 6 possible directions
  in the following order of creation: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
- `\` creates 2 bees in the following order: first bee moving to the
  upper left (dir. 2), second bee moving to the lower right (dir. 5).
- `/` creates 2 bees in the following order: first bee moving to the
  upper right (dir. 1), second bee moving to the lower left (dir. 4).
- `_` creates 2 bees in the following order: first bee moving to the
  right(dir. 0), second bee moving to the left (dir. 3).

During program initialization the honeycomb is scanned for these 4 instructions column by column, starting in the upper left corner and ending in the lower right corner of the honeycomb.

A beeswax program may contain an arbitrary amount of these 4 instructions. All created bees are pushed on an IP stack, so the first bee executing code after initialization is the last bee that got pushed onto the IP stack.
After initialization, the creation instructions have no effect on program execution anymore and get ignored by the bees if they encounter these instructions.

---

**Length 0 snippet**

Invalid program. Beeswax demands at least one instruction for IP creation, no matter how large the program is. The interpreter stops with an error message.

```
julia> beeswax("invalid program.bswx")
ERROR: No starting point found. Not a valid beeswax program.
```

Comment: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6918/8478

Answer (score 18):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/)

This 'language' is the combination of an interpreted language, GP, a C library called PARI, and a REPL called gp. It is a domain-specific language, specializing in algebraic number theory. You can do math very easily in GP, but some things (like string manipulation) are impractical.

Length 1: `'`

This command can be used to quote, but not in the usual way. `'x` means "the literal polynomial x, not the value in the variable x". In postfix, it means the derivative. Tricky example: `'x'` is 1 -- the derivative of the polynomial x. (But it is the 0th-degree polynomial 1, not the integer 1: `'x'==1` is true, but `'x'===1` is false since `type('x')` is `"t_POL"` not `"t_INT"`.) `'` can also be used on functions, where it means the numerical derivative: `sin'(x)` is the same as `cos(x)`, up to roundoff error at least.

Length 2: `<-`

This command is used in set-builder notation. If you want to take a vector `v` and select only those values which satisfy `f(x)`, you can run `[x | x <- v, f(x)]`. You can also use `[g(x) | x <- v, f(x)]` to apply the function `g` to all such terms.

Length 3: `Mod`

Most languages have a modulus operator, but GP also has the command `Mod`, which converts a number into an [integer-mod-m](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) object. You can then do exponentiation, division, and other operations naturally, and they are fast. So `(99^8388607)%8388607` is slow (2 seconds) while `Mod(99, 8388607)^8388607` is fast (less than a microsecond). You can also use this to do modular inversion using the extended Euclidean algorithm: `1/Mod(3,7)` gives `Mod(5,7)` because (3*5)%7 = 1. (See also `gcdext`.)

Length 4: `fold`

This command allows a vector to be combined pairwise with a given function. Note that some functions already fold automatically where that would be useful: `lcm`, `gcd`, `Str`, and (in some sense) `chinese`.

Length 5: `3^3^3`

This yields 7625597484987, demonstrating not only that `^` represents exponentiation rather than a bitwise operator but that exponentiation is right-associative. This is the mathematical convention, but many other languages are left-associative instead, giving the much smaller 19683. See [PARI/GP Operator Precedence](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Operator_precedence#PARI.2FGP) or section 2.4 in the [User's Guide to PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari/manuals/2.7.0/users.pdf).

Length 6: `fordiv`

GP has many types of loops built in which go beyond the standard C-style `for`, `do`, and `while`. This one takes a number and loops once for each of its divisors, setting the dummy variable equal to the divisor itself. There is also the summation version `sumdiv` which adds up all the results of the inner loop. Thus `sumdiv(720720, n, n^2)` gives the sum of the squares of the divisors of 720720. (You could already do this with `sigma(720720, 2)` but this version is more customizable.) Note also that fast factorization techniques are used, not just trial division, so the result is computed quickly.

Length 7: `V ec(x)`

This demonstrates two principles of GP. First is the ability to convert between different forms with conversion commands like `Pol` (polynomial), `Vec` (vector), `Vecsmall` (vector of small integers), `Set` (set), `Mat` (matrix), etc. Second is the fact that the parser completely ignores spaces, so `V ec` is the same as `Vec`. Space is added only for readability. This can, however, have interesting effects on constrained coding!

Length 8: `eta(I/4)`

PARI/GP includes a large number of built-in special functions. eta(z) represents an infinite product (the [Dedekind eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function)) and is computed efficiently, but you can also compute this instance 'directly' as `prodinf(n=1,1-exp(-Pi*n/2))`.

Length 9: `asinh('x)`

As hinted at by the first snippet, `'` means that x is to be treated as a formal variable. (By default it, and all other variables, are purely formal, but you could also assign to it: `x=1`, for example. If you haven't assigned to it you can drop the `'`.) When the inverse hyperbolic sine function gets an argument which includes a formal variable, it computes a Maclaurin series in that variable, so this results in `x - 1/6*x^3 + ...` where the terms continue depending on your settings (`default(seriesprecision)` controls these settings). You can also force GP to use a desired number of terms with the `O` command:  `asinh(x+O(x^4))`.

Length 10: `-eint1(-9)`

`eint1` is the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), which can be used (among other things!) to estimate the number of primes up to a certain number. This provides an estimate for the number of primes up to *e*<sup>9</sup>, and it's pretty good: the exact answer is 1019 and this gives about 1037.

Length 11: `teichmuller`

`teichmuller(x)` gives the [Teichmüller character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichm%C3%BCller_character) of *x*, that is, the unique (*p*-1)-th root of unity congruent to x / p^k modulo p with k maximal. PARI/GP has strong support for [class field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_field_theory) and has many nontrivial functions built in.

Length 12: `hilbert(3,5)`

Computes the [Hilbert symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_symbol) of 3 and 5. Since the third argument is not given, the command defaults to doing the calculation 'at infinity', that is, the completion is the real numbers. You could also pass a prime *p* in which case it would instead use the *p*-adic numbers as the completion.

Length 13: `thue(x^2+3,7)`

This is where GP's specialized functions begin to shine. `thue` solves a [Thue equation](http://www.math.uoc.gr/~tzanakis/Papers/PracticalSolutionThueEq.pdf), which is an [irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial) bivariate [homogeneous polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial) of degree at least 3. This example uses *x*<sup>2</sup> + 3 *y*<sup>2</sup> = 7, which has four integer solutions. This command has many additional options, for which see the help entries `??thue` and `??thueinit`. Note that although the polynomial of interest is bivariate and homogeneous, it is entered in GP as an inhomogeneous univariate polynomial. This can be achieved by setting either variable to 1.

Length 14: `Vec(eta('x)^2)`

This computes the Taylor series of the [Dedekind eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function), squares it, and returns the coefficients. This is a slick way to compute sequence [A002107](https://oeis.org/A002107) in the OEIS, the number of partitions of a number into an even number of distinct parts minus number of partitions of the same number into an odd number of distinct parts, with 2 types of each part. (Replacing the `2` in the program with a different number changes the number of parts accordingly; using 1, for instance, yields [A010815](https://oeis.org/A010815) instead.)

Note that the `'` is optional (but good form), see the length 1 snippet.

Length 15: `hyperu(-38,9,1)`

This computes 76! * (binomial(38,0)/38! - binomial(38,1)/39! + binomial(38,2)/40! - ... + binomial(38,38)/76!) using the [*U*-confluent hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function). See [A006902](http://oeis.org/A006902) in the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/).

Length 17: `lcm(znstar(n)[2])`

This computes the [Reduced totient function psi(n)](https://oeis.org/A002322).

> Length 25: `(Mod([1,1;1,0],m)^n)[1,2]`

Answer (score 18):

## Perl

**Factoid**
Perl is a general-purpose, dynamic programming language. It was created by Larry Wall in 1987 and is still widely used today. Perl is not an acronym, but there are a couple of backronyms in place, such as <s>"Pathologically Eclectic Rubbish Lister"</s> "Practical Extraction and Report Language".
**Snippet Length 1**
`;`
In Perl, semicolons mark the end of a line. Because empty lines are ignored, this program simply exits without doing anything.
**Snippet Length 2**
`1;`
`1` is a true value in Perl. In Perl modules, the code has to end with a true value, usually this ([or sometimes something rather silly](https://metacpan.org/source/MSCHWERN/AAAAAAAAA-1.01/aaa/AAAAAAAAA.pm#L105).)
**Snippet Length 3**
`&a;`
You're probably wondering: "What's that funky symbol doing there?" Well, in Perl, the `&` symbol marks the beginning of a subroutine (also known as a function). This executes the subroutine `a` and quits.
**Snippet Length 4**
`1+1;`
Any positive non-zero number is true in Perl, as well as almost any non-empty string. (`'0'` is false.) Since 1 + 1 = 2, and 2 is a positive number, this works just like the `1;` snippet.
**Length 5**
`$_=3;`
This assigns a scalar variable in Perl. See that `$`? That's what makes it a scalar. This assigns `$_` with the value 3.
**Length 6**
`print;`
There's something special about `$_`: it's Perl's default variable. Most times, if an argument is not given, it falls back to `$_`. This prints `3`, assuming you set a variable like in the length 5 snippet.
**Length 7**
`s/b/B/g`
What is THAT? Did I just take letters and add slashes? No, this is the substitution operator. What it does it is takes a little `b` and replaces it with a big `B`. The `/g` is for global, which tells it to do this for all matches. Of course, it's doing this on `$_`, Perl's default variable, but I'll show you how to do it properly later.
**Length 8**
`@l=(3,4)`
This defines an array with the items `3` and `4` in it. An `@` makes it an array, just like `$` makes it a scalar. Note that `@_` is not Perl's default array.
**Length 9**
`if(2>1){}`
The `if` conditional works as you would expect it to in other languages. It checks if the statement inside the parentheses is true, and if it is, executes the code in the brackets (in this case, none.) Note that the brackets do not have to end with a semicolon.
**Length 10**
`` $o=`cat A` ``
In Perl, backticks can be used to get the output of a command. Here, it gets the contents of the file "A" (from the `cat` command.)

Comment: Length 8 is incorrect. It gives you an array with one array ref in it.

Comment: @skibrianski Thanks for pointing that out, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 18):

## Fishing

[Fishing](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fishing) is a 2-D programming language created by OriginalOldMan in 2013.

**Factoid**

This language is based off of "fish" that a "fisherman" catches as he walks along a "dock." Fishing implements a memory tape similar to that of Brainfuck.

*Note: Since Fishing is very byte-inefficient and that programs with odd byte count are impossible, the length refers to the number of characters used to define the dock. The dock begins after the initial direction walking, direction casting, and casting length of 1 have been set.*

**Dock Length 0**

```
v+
```

This sets the fisherman to cast his line down by 1 space. The direction the fisherman casts is determined by `v`, `>`, `<`, and `^`. The length of the line being casted must be a positive integer to work. It is controlled by `+` and `-`. By default, the fisherman begins walking east. The commands for the direction the fisherman walks are `[` to go east, `]` to go west, `|` to go north, and `_` to go south.

**Dock Length 1**

```
>+CI
```

This sets the first cell on the tape equal to the user input. Note that the fisherman is casting to the east.

**Dock Length 2**

```
v+CC
  IN
```

This is cat. The user input will be printed with a trailing newline.

**Dock Length 3**

```
v+CCC
  `A`
```

This assigns the string `A` to the first cell on the tape.

When the fisherman catches a tick, the string between the ticks is assigned to the first cell (and can be printed with `P` or `N`).

**Dock Length 4**

```
>+_
  C`
  C3
  C`
  Cn
```

Look! Our first example of the fisherman not walking east for the entire program. Like in the snippet with dock length 2, the fisherman will cast west. However, he will also be walking south. Here, the command to walk south must occur after the fisherman receives the information that he is casting to the right by 1, or there will be an error.

In order to have a manipulatable number on the tape, the number must be entered as a string and later be converted into a decimal with `n`.

**Dock Length 5**

```
v+CCCCC
  `ab`r
```

The string `ab` is put on the tape, and `r` is used to reverse it. Note that `r` cannot reverse a number *if the command* `n` *has been used on the number*. Thus, `r` will work for the fish  `` `12`r `` but not for  `` `12`nr ``.

After the above program, the tape contains the string `ba`.

**Dock Length 6**

```
    a `N
v+C^CDCC
  `
```

Here, we see a couple modifications to the dock itself. The direction of casting is changed from south to north by `^`. We also see `D` for the first time. `D` does not have any function but to keep the fisherman walking on the dock. The fisherman does not cast or change direction. The only function of `D` is for space.

The above program prints `a` with a trailing newline.

**Dock Length 7**

```
v+CCCCCCC
  `4`{`1`
```

Fishing works through a series of cells on a tape. It's about time we see implementation of multiple cells. The above code assigns `4` to the first cell, moves to the right by one cell with `{` (moving to the left is done with `}`), and assigns `1` to the second cell.

**Dock Length 8**

```
v+CCCCCCCC
  `185`nSN
```

We should recognize `n` and `N` from before, but `S` is new. `S` squares the value in the current cell. The above program will print `34225`, which is equal to `185^2`.

**Dock Length 9**

```
v+CCCCCCCCC
  `2015`l{N
```

`l` is an interesting fish. It finds the length of the current cell and adds it to the end of the tape. The above code will print the length of the string `2015`, which is `4`.

**Dock Length 10**

```
v+CCC+CCC+CC
`p`ersonally
unliquidated
disjunction`
liver`morium
```

One of the cool things about Fishing is that it is really easy to obfuscate messages, such as above or in [this obfuscated `Hello, World!`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54807/the-programming-language-quiz/55259#55259). The fisherman does not need to catch all of the fish in the program, as seen above. Any characters in the pond that are not caught are simply ignored.

The above program puts `eridan` on the tape. The `er` in `personally`, the `ida` in `unliquidated`, and the `n` in `disjunction` are used. Another grid that would put `eridan` on the tape is here.

```
v+CCC+CCC+CC
..`er.......
......ida...
..........n`
```

**Dock Length 12**

```
v+CCCCCCCCCCCC
  `9`n{`8`n}aP
```

We can finally have non-arbitrary interactions with other cells on the tape without the value of the second cell depending on the value of the first. We achieve this with `a`, which adds the value of the cell to the right on the tape to the current cell on the tape. The above will set the value of the first cell to the integer `9`, set the value of the second cell to the integer `8`, then replace the first cell with `17`, and print it.

**Dock Length 16**

```
v+CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
  `Hello, World!`P
```

There it is: `Hello, World!` This should be the shortest version there is.

---

Unfortunately, since Fishing isn't that high-tech of a language, my answer will stop here. Thank you all very much for upvoting!

Comment: Heh, of course you'd do a fish-themed language,

Comment: @Deusovi I'm going to be perfectly honest here - I never realized the irony of that.

Comment: My goal for this answer is just to get to 16 so I can post `Hello, World!`

Comment: @ANerd-I 2 more to go 'till 16...

Comment: @ANerd-I You're 14 total votes now.

Answer (score 17):

### Tcl

Unlike many other languages, Tcl has no reserved words, the control structures are just "normal" commands.

#### 2 chars

```
{}
```

Empty string literal.

#### 5 chars

```
end-1
```

Used as index, means the second last element.

#### 6 chars

```
if 0 ?
```

Just a comment. Can span multiple lines.

Comment: I think you should add the `{}`, `end-1`.

Answer (score 17):

### T-SQL

Factoid: T-SQL is in fact Turing-Complete and can be proven (given enough upvotes).

Comment: how many upvote do you need? XD

Comment: Here is my upvote. Now prove it! Just kidding, but you still have my upvote.

Comment: at 8 characters I think you can actually run a command? `SELECT 1`

Comment: Since the snippets don't have to be complete programs, just snippets, there are a number of things that could be done.  `;` is the standard terminator, although it is optional for most statements in T-SQL. `--` indicates the beginning of a single line comment. `SET` can be used to assign values to variables and alter database and system parameters. `/**/` defines a comment block.  `BREAK` exits a loop. `sp_who` is a system procedure that provide information on users and processes.  Please put something up for our upvotes.

Answer (score 17):

## Fortran

**Factoid:** The first Fortran (then called FORTRAN) compiler was created at IBM in 1957. Programs were originally submitted on punch cards.

---

**Length 7:**

```
       ​
```

"What am I looking at?" one might wonder. Why, that's seven spaces, of course! "Okay, why seven spaces? That's a dumb choice for a snippet." Perhaps, but it illustrates an important concept in early versions of Fortran: all code other than labeled lines and comments had to begin on column 7.

Here is an example of FORTRAN 77 code that exemplifies this and a couple other concepts we've seen thus far:

```
C      This is going to be so cool, guys
C      We gonna compute so many GCDs, just you wait
       PROGRAM GCD(A, B)
         N = A
         M = B
100      IF (M .NE. 0) THEN
           I = N
           N = M
           M = MOD(I, M)
           GOTO 100
         END IF
         GCD = N
         RETURN
       END
```

Note the `GOTO` within the loop. It's acting as a while loop, which was eventually implemented as `do while` in Fortran 90, but was unavailable in FORTRAN 77.

---

**Length 6:**

```
12HABC
```

Early versions of Fortran had no `character` type. To manipulate strings, one had to use [Hollerith constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollerith_constant), which themselves are typeless but can be stored in numeric variables. Hollerith constants begin with the length of the string in bytes, then `H`, then the string contents.

In this example we have `12HPCG`, which allocates 12 bytes for the string `PCG`. Since we've allocated more than we've provided, the actual string that gets used is `"PCG         "`. In such situations, the provided string is left-justified within the field and padded with spaces to fill the allocated length.

---

**Length 5:**

```
!$omp
```

Fine grain parallelism, anyone? You can invoke OpenMP using the directive `!$omp`, assuming you've compiled the program with OpenMP enabled. If you haven't, notice how the directive begins with an exclamation point. As we saw in snippet 4 below, this marks a comment. So if OpenMP isn't enabled, the compiler just sees this as a comment.

One of the most common uses of OpenMP in Fortran is the `parallel do` loop. A toy example:

```
!$omp parallel do
do i = 1, n
    y(i) = 10*x(i) + 1
end do
!$omp end parallel do
```

This will spawn up to `omp_get_num_threads()` threads, each performing a single iteration of the loop in parallel.

---

**Length 4:**

```
type
```

Fortran has derived data types! I'm not sure how long that's been available, but it's at least been present since Fortran 95. Types are defined like so:

```
type dog
    character(10) :: breed
    real :: age
end type dog
```

You can then declare, assign, and access variables of this type.

```
! Declare Lucy as a dog
type(dog) :: Lucy

! Tell me about Lucy
Lucy = dog('Newfie', 8.1)

! What's Lucy's breed?
her_breed = Lucy%breed
```

Note the exclamation points: that's the more modern of the two ways to include a comment in Fortran. The other is to put `C` in the first column of the line.

---

**Length 3:**

```
end
```

Of course `end` is boring. However, if you're writing a program in Fortran, you'll find yourself writing `end` all over the place: `end do`, `end if`, `end program`, `end function`, `end subroutine`, etc. So aspiring Fortran users beware: the `end` is entirely inescapable.

---

**Length 2:**

```
::
```

You'll probably find it difficult to get by without declaring a few variables. That's where the double colon comes in!

Say you're writing a subroutine that takes an argument `a`. You can tell Fortran a bit about `a` by saying, for example, `real(8), intent(in), parameter :: a`. This declares `a` to be a fixed 8-byte real input that won't be returned. Note the colons separating the attributes from the variable. Now if you were to also declare a variable `b` that isn't an argument, it's just a plain old real, you can omit the colons: `real(8) b`. The colons are only required if you're specifying a type *and* attributes.

---

**Length 1:**

```
1
```

Who doesn't love a good `GO TO` statement? You can make a *labeled line* by putting a number in the first column. If you have a labeled line, you can `GO TO` that line using `GO TO 1`.

Comment: Shame I didn't see this or think of it sooner. I love fortran.

Answer (score 17):

## GolfScript

Weird how nobody's done this one yet, as it's quite popular on this site.

#### Factoid

Written and released in 2007, [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/) is probably the first esoteric programming language invented for the purpose of code golf. Since then, it's inspired [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), [Pyth](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pyth), [Rebmu](http://rebmu.hostilefork.com/), [gs2](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2), and maybe others.

#### 1 character

```
,
```

GolfScript is a stack-based language, and all of standard input is pushed onto the stack when the program starts. The `,` command pops a value, and, if it is an array or string, pushes back its length. At the end of the program, every value on the stack is printed, bottom-to-top. Thus, this program calculates the **length** of whatever input you pass it, like `wc -c`! Our 1-character program is already a useful tool.

#### 2 characters

```
~~
```

This program **prints the bitwise NOT** of a number given on standard input. For example, when you pass it a file containing `5`, it will print `-6`.

This, of course, showcases a trick GolfScript uses to cut down code size: not only does it assign operations to lots of single ASCII characters, it also assigns *multiple* meanings to each character depending on the type(s) of the value(s) popped.

For example, `~` on strings is `eval()`, which is the simplest way to read a number from a string in GolfScript. It pops a string and executes it as code, pushing back an integer in our case. Applying `~` again to this integer, it does something very different: namely, compute the bitwise NOT of the given value and push it back.

#### 3 characters

```
-1%
```

This program **reverses standard input.** `-1` pushes -1 to the stack, and `<string> <int> %` corresponds to Python's `string[::n]` behavior: it steps through characters from the string from one end to another with the given step size.

#### 4 characters

```
{+}*
```

This is the idiomatic GolfScript to write `sum()`, i.e., the sum of values in an array (or string, which is just a special kind of array). It will sum together the ASCII values in the standard input string, or whichever list is on top of the stack. `{+}` is a block, representing some GolfScript code (`+`), and it is folded `*` over its bottom argument. This has a precise meaning:

```
    [a b c d e] {∘} *

==  a b ∘ c ∘ d ∘ e ∘
```

i.e., it is a [left fold](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fold) with the first element of the list as the initial value.

#### 5 characters

```
2base
```

Ironically, GolfScript has commands that are longer than one character, for... no reason at all. (Well, when I asked Darren about it in an email, a long time ago, he said he simply didn't want the language to be frustrating to program in, and keywords like `and`, `or` and `base` are probably easier to remember than single characters!)

The `base` command takes a positive base *n* as an argument, and performs a conversion between lists of base-*n* digits and integer values. Applying `2base` to a list like `[1 1 0]` will yield `6`, and vice versa.

#### 6 characters

```
n/.&n*
```

`n` pushes a newline to the stack, and `/` and `*` are the split/join commands to convert between lists and strings. So, this first splits the input string into lines, does something to that list of lines, and joins it back into one long string with newline characters in it.

But what does it do? `.` is a stack operation that duplicates the top element on the stack, which is now our list of lines, twice. `&` will pop these two lists and compute their [set intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)). That's sort of weird; we're computing *L ∩ L*, which set theory tells us is just *L*. This is a little GolfScript trick, though (and it also works in CJam): the implementation simply calls Ruby's `&`, which does the same, and has the additional result of **removing duplicates** from the list, while preserving their order.

So we have a 6-character program to remove duplicate lines from standard input.

#### 7 characters

```
{,}$-1=
```

`[list] [block] $` is "sort by", which is a very powerful tool: it will sort the array by whatever function the block represents. Here, `,` is "length", and the snippet expects a list of strings on top of the stack. It will sort the list by length, and then extract the final element (`-1=` indexes the list) to find the **longest string in the list**.

#### 8 characters

```
":n`":n`
```

The shortest GolfScript [quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)). Note that e.g. `1` isn’t a *real* quine: that prints `1\n`! How does this all make sense?

At the end of program execution, GolfScript [wraps the current stack in a `GArray`](https://github.com/mtolly/golfscript/blob/master/test/golfscript.rb#L487) and evaluates `puts`, which is by default defined as `print n print`.

What we do, then, is assign the string `` ":n`" `` to `n`, and then inspect (`` ` ``) it to push `` "\":n`\"" `` on the stack. The implicit printing of `n` that happens at the end of our program is now exactly what we need to finish our quine!

#### 9 characters

```
"#{size}"
```

GolfScript is implemented in Ruby, and it [uses `eval`](https://github.com/mtolly/golfscript/blob/master/test/golfscript.rb#L401) to read its string literals. This means you can “statically” call any Ruby code you want! In this case, the `size` method call is evaluated on `"\"#{size}\""` (I’m not sure why) and the result is the string `"9"`. That string is, again, implicitly printed, so this program just outputs its own size: `9`.

#### 10 characters

```
{9(:9.(}do
```

This prints:

```
87654321
```

First, `do` is one of GolfScript’s flow control structures: `{thing}do` in pseudocode is like `do { thing } while popStack() is truthy`. Our `thing` is `9(:9.(`. That’s `push 9`, `decrement`, `assign to 9` (yes!), `duplicate`, `decrement`.

The assignment to `9` is the tricky bit! Pushing an integer literal [isn’t exempt from a variable lookup](https://github.com/mtolly/golfscript/blob/master/test/golfscript.rb#L402) in GolfScript; when you push `9` for the first time, a variable called `9` gets assigned the value of `t.to_i == 9` on the fly. There’s not actually much special about this variable, and as you can see, assigning to it is A-OK.

(This is actually useful: instead of starting with `0:x;` and then updating `x` a lot, you can often just work with `0` itself as a pre-initialized variable.)

As a condition, we have `.(`: loop until whatever is on the stack, minus one, is falsey, i.e. zero. So we push decrements of `9` until they reach `1`, i.e. `8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`. These all get printed after each other without spaces in-between by the implicit *wrap-and-`print`* at the end of the program.

Comment: +1 can we have some more?

Answer (score 17):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy)

I've been wanting to put this up for ages. Here we go...

## Factoid:

Vitsy is a stack-based 1D programming language with a stack composed of stacks composed of doubles. At any point, the program stack may look like this:

```
4 8 9      As you can see, each sub-stack may have its own unique length.
8 3 2
9 6 4      Items from the current stack will always be pulled from the top, unless 
3   3      otherwise specified by the user.
5
```

These would technically be doubles, but, hey, it's a representation.

## Length 1 Snippet:

```
[
```

The shortest stack overflow error you'll ever see.

Basically, in Vitsy, the `[` represents "start while loop". While in a while loop, the program will wrap around the line - which means it starts another while loop, which wraps around the line and starts another while...

You get it.

## Length 2 Snippet:

```
"N
```

Prints the number 78 to STDOUT.

The character `"` captures any characters following it as a string and pushes it to the stack. Whenever Vitsy is capturing text, it wraps around the line. Therefore, `N` is pushed to the stack. Then, the character `N` prints the top item of the stack to STDOUT. ASCII Character 78 is `N`, therefore, 78 is printed to STDOUT.

## Length 3 Snippet

Length 3... in characters.

```
'Nߟ
```

Since Vitsy reads unknown characters as NOPs and can read character values of UTF-8, the character `ߟ` translates to the number `2015`.

Happy late welcome to 2015, everybody.

## Length 4 Snippet

```
I\iO
```

Just in case you ever want to reverse an input, this will grab the input a character at a time, reversing the string in the process.

## Length 5 Snippet

```
DmN
0
```

This code will *always* error unless the number `1` is input.

`m` tells the program to go to a line specified by the top item of the stack. If the number is `0`, it'll duplicate the top item and go to the `0`th line, the line with the `m` in it. This will throw the standard StackOverflowException. If it's `1`, it'll go to the first line (`0`), push `0` to the stack, go back to where it left off (`N`), and push the top item of the stack to STDOUT as a number (`0`). If it's greater than one, or less than 0, it'll throw an ArrayOutOfBoundsException, because it doesn't know where to look for the specified line.

## Length 6 Snippet

The standard quine is simply:

```
'rd3*Z
'      Capture all items as string until encountering another one
       of itself. If it does not find it before the end of the 
       line, it will loop around the line back to the start,
       which makes this capture all of the instructions as a string.
 r     Reverse the current stack
  d3*  Get the ASCII number of '
     Z Print everything in the stack out as a character.
```

I love how short this is, and it was totally unintentional. :D

## Length 7 Snippet

```
DpD(!<N
```

This program will print out a single zero if the number input is not prime, and infinite 0s if it is prime. Basically, it tests if a number is prime. If it is, it skips the `<`, which forces a backward loop (which will always find `0` because `1`, the truthy for the prime number test, is not prime.

## Length 8 Snippet

```
R\&Yv?vN
```

I just realized I haven't introduced stack features. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Vitsy also has stack manipulators - in this example, I grab input as an integer implicitly, get a random decimal in the range [0,20) and generate that number (when looping, we use the truncated integer as the repeat count) many times. Note that this will be in the range [1, 20], as there is already a stack.

## Length 9 Snippet:

```
00k
;use a
```

So, let's say that you want to use another program (called "a") in your program. So what do you do?

You import it with `;use`. Then, you get the 0th index of the `;use` declaration's 0th line of code (`00k`). Very fancy classes. This will be the basis in which I will create libraries for [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy). (Note that this is now `;u` - the declarations were changed to only the first letter as of a later update)

## Length 10 Snippet:

What's the date again?

```
")(etaD"nZ
```

[Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy) doesn't have it's own way of getting the date - but it does have JavaScript eval worked into the code. That means that I can get the date string that JavaScript returns by pushing `Date()` to the stack, then eval with JS (`n`), then outputting the entire stack (`Z`). Fun, huh?

## Length 11 Snippet

It's getting harder to make these. D:

```
iG' ystiv',
```

Well, this code is not fun. If you have [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy) saved as a system command (like I do), you can have problems like this. Basically, I grab the filename and push it to the stack with `iG` (push -1, get that index of class name), then I push 'vitsy ' behind it. Then I execute that in a shell.

[image: forkbomb]

Forkbomb = sad

## Length 14 Snippet

```
v&v\[y1-\?v?v]
```

What I'm doing here is moving a prompted input number of items to a following stack. This would likely be used in a non-runnable class like so:

```
;
v&v\[y1-\?v?v]
```

And called like so:

```
01k
;u something.vt
```

Explanation:

I grab the top item of the stack (my number of items to move), make a new stack, push that number back in and repeat everything in the loop brackets that many times. `y1-` signifies the number of stacks currently in play minus one, so `y1-\?` goes to the stack previous of the one you're currently in (because `I'm an idiot` and never implemented going backwards - but don't worry, it'll be here soon).

## Length 15 Snippet - Fibonacci!

```
11[XD{+DN' 'O1]
```

This outputs the fibonacci sequence, separated by spaces, to STDOUT infinitely.

Interestingly enough, while making this code the first time, I realized that separating by spaces (with a small delay between each output) caused [parabolas to appear in the output](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416854/parabolas-in-sequences-of-digits-from-the-fibonacci-sequence). Go figure.

Comment: How come `Date()` is backwards in length 10?

Comment: [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy) is a top access only stack. When I do eval, it grabs it in reverse order of how I put it into the stack. That means that `)(etaD` is read as `Date()` by eval. @GamrCorps

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina)

#### Factoid:

Retina is based on regular expressions, and supports various stages like match, replace, split, grep, antigrep, transliteration, and sort.

### 0 bytes:

Counts chars in input...+1!

### 1 byte:

```
1
```

Counts the number of `1`s in the input. Pretty boring, but can make quick unary to decimal conversion.

### 2 bytes:

```
.+
```

Outputs the number of nonempty lines in the input.

### 3 bytes:

```
\d
```

Deletes numbers[.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48207/shortest-sorted-hello-world) (Tip: If you want empty lines to show in code, use <pre> tags.)

### 4 bytes:

```
1
$_
```

Computes squares. (Unary in, unary out)

### 5 bytes:

```
T`l`L
```

UPPERCASES YOUR TEXT.

### 6 bytes:

```
G`cats
```

Finds the [cats]

### 7 bytes:

```
\d
$*
1
```

Sums digits in input.

### 8 bytes:

```
^
1
1
$'
```

Computes triangular numbers. (Unary in, unary out)

### 9 bytes:

```
(.)\1+
$1
```

Dereplicates chars.

### 10 bytes:

```
S`.
¶+
$.0
```

Counts chars in a slightly weird way. (The shortest way is 3 characters.)

### 11 bytes:

```
(^x|\1xx)+$
```

Matches squares.

### 14 bytes:

```
\(*S1`
\(*S1`
```

[The shortest Retina quine.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67428/51443)

### 15 bytes:

```
1
$`$'2
2
$_1
1
```

Computes cubes. (Unary in, decimal out)

Comment: A few corrections: `O\`.` sorts all the non-linefeed characters of the input, even across lines. `S`.+` is a split stage which means it doesn't count anything but gives you a string of `M + N - 1` linefeeds, where `M` is the number of non-empty lines and `N` is the number of lines in total. Also I'm not sure what you mean by "dereplicating chars" but the last snippet just replaces each line with its last character.

Comment: The last example will actually find a match in any input, because it can simply match the end of the string as an empty match. (Of course that still sort of helps to distinguish non-squares from squares.) This could be fixed by either matching positive squares with `+` instead of `*` or by prepending `^` to ensure the entire string is matched.

Comment: Your 9 byte program can be written in 3 bytes: ```D`.```

Comment: Nope. `xxyyxx`.

Comment: `.+` only counts non-empty lines. Triangular numbers can be calculated in 5 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fkEtF3RBIAQEA "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 17):

## HQ9+

**Factoid:**

[HQ9+](http://esolangs.org/wiki/HQ9%2B) is a joke programming language, invented by Cliff L. Biffle in 2001. It is a golfing language, that has a very small source code for the most common programming exercises, due to its small set of strategic built-ins.

**Length 1**

```
Q
```

HQ9+ has a very short quine. The `Q` built-in prints the source code of the entire program.

**Length 2**

```
9+
```

Speaking about crazy built-ins, HQ9+ is almost comparable to Mathematica. This program prints the entire lyrics of "99 bottles of beer on the wall", before it increments the accumulator and terminates.

**Length 3**

```
9H9
```

Commands can be mixed and matched in any order you want. This program, for instance, takes a break and greats the world between two passes through the already mentioned song "99 bottles of beer on the wall."

**Length 4**

```
HQ9+
```

Yup, The name of the language is actually a syntactically valid program by itself. One thing to notice here is how `Q` behaves when there are other characters in the program as well. In between hello world and 99 bottles of beer, it prints "HQ9+". While not a quine, the source code is at least part of the output.

**Length 5**

```
+++++
```

There are no other operations than `+` that can be applied to the accumulator. Thus, if we want to increase it by five, this is the shortest way to do it. While backwards compatible with HQ9+, the popular object-oriented extension of the language by David Morgan-Mar, HQ9++, is also going to create two new subclasses of the generic superclass if this code is executed. The output is the same though.

**Length 6**

```
QH99QH
```

We have seen that HQ9+ is capable of only a limited number of outputs, however, it can still output any *information*. Using the highest density of information per command (e.g. avoid to increase the accumulator), the flow rate of information is log2(3) bits per command. For many languages, this is not known exactly, but for English text it is assumed to be [around 1.3 bits per character](http://for%20English%20text), a little less than HQ9+. I have here as an example chosen a tertiary encoding, where the output of the `H` command here represents a `0`, `Q` represents `1` and `9` represents `2`. Using that, the output of the program can be interpreted as "SE" for Stack Exchange.

**Length 7**

```
QQQQQQQ
```

Surprisingly many get this one wrong, they think `Q` prints just a Q. But Each `Q` actually prints the whole source code of the program, here resulting in

> QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
>   (49 of them)

That is a great tool for demonstrating quadratic growth, and make it possible for HQ9+ to be used in surprising ways, like in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59497/53025) printing twice the length of the program to STDOUT.

**Length 8**

```
+++Q++++
```

As the `+` command is effectively a NOP regarding output, a single `Q` placed anywhere in a string of `+` can be used to produce a quine of arbitrary length.

**Length 9**

```
BURLESQUE
```

Is this a quine or not? That depends on the interpreter used. It is not very clear in the specification if invalid characters should be ignored or not. In the interpreters that do ignore such characters, this is proper quine. Others just throw an error. That is not necessarily more correct either, as error management is not accurately specified either. (Ehm.. It is not mentioned...)

**Length 10**

```
H+H+H+H+H+
```

Many people will probably have some concerns about to language because of the very permissive specification potentially leading to spaghetti code or bad programming practises. This example is an attempt to disprove this myth by adapting principles from [structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming), by carefully incrementing the accumulator after each successfully executed statement. Each and every instruction is thus properly clarified.

**Length 12**

```
219661 beers
```

Is it still possible to find interesting long programs in HQ9+? Well, we can take a look at iterating programs. If the above snippet is run through an interpreter ignoring non-existing commands, the `9` triggers our familiar song. The output, if you analyse it, contains exactly 60 `9`'s. Suppose we feed that back as an input, we end up with 60 new runs of the song. The number grows exponentially, so after three iterations, we have reached a total of 219661. Also worth mentioning is the growth of "Hello, world!". Each run of the song spawns 101 new ones (2 per verse, one extra in "t**H**e store"), and each one produces one child in the next iterations. That should give us 369761 in total on the third iteration.

Answer (score 17):

### [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE)

**Factoid:** Pyke is a stack-based golfing language with lots of implicit inputs. It was created to be easily extendable in February 2016. [It is a great language to golf in](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9636/32686).

**1 byte:**

```
r
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=r)

This is the shortest semi-infinite loop in Pyke (Pyke has a setting that breaks out of it early turned on by default). It is equivalent to

```
1: GOTO_START
```

`r` has 2 defined functions - goto_start and return. If `r` is visited in a function macro, it will instead return the current values on the stack.

If an error occurs whilst redoing the code again, it will go back to `r` and continue onwards.

**2 bytes:**

```
SB
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=SB&input=5)

The factorial function - not a builtin. Equivalent to

```
product(range(1, input+1))
```

Input is implicit in Pyke, whenever input is missing, it loads the next value off the input stack onto the program stack. At the end of the input stack there is an infinite amount of whatever the first item was. Output in Pyke is also implicit. Explicit output can also be used with the newline and `p` nodes for with and without a trailing newline respectively.

**3 bytes:**

```
]UP
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%5DUP&input=10&warnings=0)

This actually shows off 3 interesting features:

```
]   -   [input, input] - Pyke reuses the stack when already used
 U  -  2d_map(^) - Creates a 2d range, effectively an `a*b` grid
  P - pretty_print(^) - Pretty print the values keeping the same padding for every column
```

**4 bytes**

```
F\_+
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=F%5C_%2B&input=Hello+World%21&warnings=0)

This shows off Pyke's for-loops using strings. If the input to a for loop is a string and the output is a list of strings, it automatically concatinates them together. Equivalent to

```
rtn = []
for i in input:
    rtn.append(i+"_")
rtn = "".join(rtn)
print(rtn)
```

**5 bytes**

```
#.b){
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%23.b%29%7B&input=5&warnings=0)

This program outputs if the input is a Fibonacci number. It uses the `up_to` node to generate Fibonacci numbers up to the input and then decides if the input is in that list

```
      - rtn = []
      - i = 0
#  )  - while rtn[-1] <= input:
 .b   -     rtn.append(nth_fib(i))
      -     i += 1
    { - input in rtn
```

**6 bytes**

```
C695@]
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=C695%40%5D)

Pyke has a neat function for clock related queries. The `C` or 'clock' takes any amount of numbers  afterwards and returns a time-related thing for each of them.

- 6 - months
- 9 - Months of the year (1 indexed, 0 is "PADDING")
- 5 - days

The script outputs the day of the current month as well as the name of that month.

```
C695   - stack = months, month_names, days
    @  - stack = month_names[months], days
     ] - stack = [month_names[months], days]
```

**7 bytes**

Finally... We got there, an absolutely minimal 'Hello World' program. Yes that is 7 bytes, in characters it is `. d 0x02 0x0973 v`

```
.dॳv
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.d%02%E0%A5%B3v)

This uses Pyke's built in compression to stick the words 'hello' and 'world' together. `. d 0x02` says that there are 2 words to be combined and the other 2 characters say which words to use.

A compressor for Pyke can be found [here](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/dictionary)

**8 bytes**

```
1?tY/r"Z
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=1%3FtY%2Fr%22Z&warnings=0)

This introduces 2 new features: Variable modification and escaping of infinite loops.

The explanation is annotated with python code to show what each character's doing

```
         - Y = 256
     r   - try:
         -     while True:
 ? Y     -         Y = lambda: v(Y)
  t      -             lambda x: x-1
1   /    -         stack.append(1/^)
         - except:
      "Z -     stack.append("Z")
```

The `?` inplace variable modification node applies the first node to the contents of the second. Eventually `Y` will equal 0 and the `1/Y` section will raise a `ZeroDivisionError` and will jump out of the infinite while loop.

**9 bytes**

```
S#2%!)1|e
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=S%232%25%21%291%7Ce&input=%5B1%2C3%2C7%5D&warnings=0)

Takes a list of numbers and outputs the largest even number or 0 if there are no even numbers in the list.

```
S         -  sorted(input)
 #   )    - filter(V, ^):
  2%!     -  not i%2
      1|  - ^ or 1
        e - if isinstance(^, int): floor_half(^)
          - else: ^[-1]
```

This overloads the `e` node which when given a list returns the last element and when given an integer, divides it by 2 and rounds down.

**10 bytes**

```
Cy1H30M"+t
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=Cy1H30M%22%2Bt)

This uses the brand new time types to add 1 hour 30 mins to the current time and drop the date part

```
C          -   current_time()
        +  -  ^ + V
 y1H30M"   -   time(hours=1, minutes = 30)
         t - time(^)
```

**11 bytes**

```
V.X".X-+||"
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=V.X%22.X-%2B%7C%7C%22&input=5%0A%22Test%22&warnings=0)

This shows off two new instructions (There are in fact only two unique ones in the program). These are the repeat `V` and the print_grid `.X` functions.

`V` takes an integer or iterable and repeats the code the length of that iterable or the number of times. It takes the whole stack and when it loops, the current stack is kept and fed as input. If an iterable is passed, it also pushes that iterable at the beginning.

`.X` is a special function in that it will probably only be used in challenges requiring a strict output format. It takes a string (with optional newlines) and pads it so it is in a grid-like format. It also optionally takes up to 8 characters to pad with:

> 0: upper (all characters have this as default)
>
> 1: topleft (corners if undefined have this)
>
> 2: left line
>
> 3: right line
>
> 4: lower line
>
> 5: topright corner
>
> 6: bottomright corner
>
> 7: bottomleft corner

If no characters are given, it defaults to surrounding the entire thing with spaces. The program can stop defining extra characters by ending with a `"`.

```
V           - repeat number of times:
 .X"        -  surround with spaces
    .X-+||" -  surround in a ascii box
```

**12 bytes**

Whoever said golfing languages had far to many useless builtins?

```
CB"Jupiter"@
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=CB%22Jupiter%22%40)

Returns the distance Jupiter will be from Earth on the next full moon (in AU). Seriously.

```
C            -   current_time()
 B           -  full_moon_after(^)
  "Jupiter"@ - distance_to_earth("Jupiter", time=^)
```

Also works for all the planets in the solar system as well as some artificial satellites such as `Voyager 2` and `PIONEER 10`

**13 bytes**

```
~1#_P)D3M*+mP
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%7E1%23_P%29D3M%2a%2BmP)

We've just gone infinite! Returns an infinite list of all the prime numbers combined with all numbers with 2 prime factors.

```
~1            -    An infinite list of all the natural numbers, starting from 0.
  #  )        -   filter(^ as i, V)
   _P         -    is_prime(^)
      D3      -  duplicate ^ 3 times
        M*    -   cartesian_product(^ * ^) (Return an infinite list of all numbers with 2 prime factors)
          +   -  ^ + ^^ (Return an infinite list with a semi-sorted transposition of the 2 input ones)
           mP - map(factors, ^) (Return an infinite list of the factors of the 1 and 2 factor numbers)
```

Infinite lists are effectively Python's generators. At the end of a Pyke program, all infinite lists on the stack are unwound as far as it will go in the time limit available (or none if done offline). Pyke has operators to filter and map nodes to infinite lists as well as combine them in various ways. Infinite lists are a relatively new feature and have been used in several short answers.

**14 bytes**

```
y0:0"wVs5
​
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=y0%3A0%22w%F0%95%86%A0Vs5%0A)

Prints out every second in a day. This could be useful for challenges where you have to filter by specific seconds.

```
y0:0"         - create the time "0:0" (0 hours and 0 minutes)
     w      -  86400. Takes the ordinate of `` - 32.
        V     - repeat ^ times: V
         s5   -   increment the seconds by 1
           \n -  print(^)
```

Both `s` and `l` change the amount of time by a predetermined amount. `s` increases and `l` decreases.

> 0 - years
>
> 1 - months
>
> 2 - days
>
> 3 - hours
>
> 4 - minutes
>
> 5 - seconds
>
> 6 - weeks
>
> 7 - 4 years
>
> 8 - decades
>
> 9 - 12 hours

**15 bytes**

```
.dȇጾȞĶl5
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.d%05%C8%87%E1%8C%BE%C8%9E%0E%C4%B6l5)

Again another dictionary command. It's up to you to understand what it does

Answer (score 17):

## ///

/// is a minimalist Turing-complete esoteric programming language. The only operation is repeated string substitution, using the syntax `/pattern/replacement/`.

**Factoid**

/// was proved Turing-complete by Ørjan Johansen in 2009, who created an interpreter for the Turing-complete language [Bitwise Cyclic Tag](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Bitwise_Cyclic_Tag).

<sup>(from http://esolangs.org/wiki////)</sup>

You can test the snippets [here](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/), or click their header.

[**Length 1**](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=4piD&input=)

```
☃
```

There's not much that can be done with one character in this language, so have a unicode snowman.

[**Length 2**](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=XG4&input=)

```
\n
```

This won't print a newline. A `\` in this language means that it'll print the next character, so it'll print a `n`. `\`s are used mostly for printing `/`s, like this: [`\/`](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=XC8&input=).

[**Length 3**](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=Ly8v&input=)

```
///
```

This is an infinite loop that does nothing, and is also the language name. It keeps replacing nothing with nothing.

[**Length 4**](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L-KYgy8v&input=) ★

```
/☃//
```

This attempts to replace a snowman with nothing/remove every snowman. Since the entire source code, except the `/☃//` part, doesn't contain a snowman, it doesn't do anything.

**Alternative Length 4** ★

```
/ //
```

Unary addition! Put both numbers on the right side of the snippet. (since /// can't take input) Like this: [`/ //00000 000`](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=LyAvLzAwMDAwIDAwMA&input=)

[**Length 5**](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=4piDL-KYgy8v&input=)

```
☃/☃//
```

This snippet is important for showing one thing: string substitution doesn't work on anything that comes before the `/pattern/replacement/`.

If you take a look at snippet length 4, it removes every snowman. But that won't work if there are snowmen before the `/pattern/replacement/`, so he stays there and get printed.

However, this snippet would remove the snowman, because the snowman comes after the `/pattern/replacement/` part: [`/☃//☃`](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L-KYgy8v4piD&input=).

**Alternative Length 5** ★

```
/\///
```

This snippet completely breaks the language. It works by removing every `/`.

[Try it here.](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L1wvLy8KCi81LzAwMDAwLwo1&input=)

[**Length 6**](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=Lwov4piDLwo&input=)

```
/
/☃/
(newline)
```

Remember the second snippet? Instead of writing `\n`, you use a literal new line.

Because Markdown apparently doesn't like empty lines of code, you have to remove the `(newline)` part when trying this in [Try it online!](http://tryitonline.net) or any other /// interpreter.

You probably guessed it by now, but I'll explain it anyways. The `/\n/☃/` part replaces every newline with a snowman. Since there's a trailing new line in the snippet, it gets replaced by a snowman and printed.

This is probably kinda boring, but don't worry, I have something more interesting planned for the seventh snippet :-)

[**Length 7**](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L-KYgy_imIM4L-KYgw&input=)

```
/☃/☃8/☃
```

This is an infinite loop. More interesting than the sixth snippet IMO.

When /// finds a `/pattern/replacement/`, it will keep replacing `pattern` with `replacement` until there are no more `pattern`s to be replaced. Therefore, if `replacement` contains `pattern`, it will always end up on an infinite loop.

There will always be a snowman to get replaced with a snowman and a badly drawn snowman:

```
☃
(☃)
☃8
(☃)8
☃88
(☃)88
☃888
...
```

**Alternative Length 7** ★

```
/0 0/ /
```

Unary subtraction! Put the numbers in this order: `largest smallest`, like this: [`/0 0/ /0000000 00000`](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=LzAgMC8gLzAwMDAwMDAgMDAwMDA&input=)

[**Length 8**](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L-KYgy9cLy9c4piD&input=)

```
/☃/\//\☃
```

Yay, 8 upvotes! An eight is the number that looks the most like a snowman.

The `/☃/\//` part replaces every snowman with a `/`. So you will probably think that if I place a snowman in the code, it'll print a `/`. Wrong.

Since `/`s are used for repeated string substitution, you'll have to put a `\` before the `/` (in this case, the `☃`) if you wanna print it.

This may seem obvious, but I forgot it once and spent some minutes trying to find the bug in my code.

[**Length 9**](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L-KYgy9cXFxcL-KYgw&input=)

```
/☃/\\\\/☃
```

The `/☃/\\\\/` part replaces every snowman with two `\` (Since `\\` is only one `\`, `\\\\` is actually `\\`).

There's only one snowman after that, so it gets replaced by the two `\`.

Finally, the two `\` turn into only one `\` and that gets printed.

[**Length 10**](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L-KYgy84L-KYgy84L0I&input=)

```
/☃/8/☃/8/B
```

If you pay attention, the second replacement is incomplete. The first replacement replaces a snowman with an eight.

The second replacement doesn't do anything, since it's incomplete. Syntax errors don't exist in ///, so nothing happens. If you don't believe me, turn on debug on TIO.

[**Length 11**](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L-KYgy84Ly84L-KYgy_imIM&input=)

```
/☃/8//8/☃/☃
```

I just realized today is 11/11, I'm adding snippet length 11 and this post has 11 upvotes...

I don't think there is anything important left to showcase about this language, /// is very simple. But I'll still try to add more snippets.

This is probably obvious, but replacements can modify other replacements.

The first replacement replaces every snowman with an eight:

```
/8/☃/☃
/8/(☃)/(☃)
/8/8/8
```

This is an infinite loop (`/8/8/`), since there will always be an eight to be replaced.

[**Length 12**](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L-KYgy9cLzhcLy_imINCLw&input=) ★

```
/☃/\/8\//☃B/
```

Making replacements with replacements! `/☃/\/8\//` replaces `☃` with `/8/`:

```
☃B/
(☃)B/
/8/B/
```

As you can see, this is now a replacement. It replaces every `8` after it with `B`.

---

A snippet with a ★ means that it requires "input" (place input on the right side of the code) and it won't do anything by itself.

Comment: What did you plan for the 7th snippet?

Comment: the alternate fifth doesn't have the backslash

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon fixed

Answer (score 17):

## [The Lambda Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus)

#### Factoid:

The lambda calculus (specifically, the untyped lambda calculus) is, according to Wikipedia, "a formal system in mathematical logic for expressing computation based on function abstraction and application using variable binding and substitution." It was published by mathematician [Alonzo Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alonzo_Church), of whom Alan Turing was a student, in 1936, and is equivalent to a Turing machine—that is, any problem solvable with an algorithm can be solved with this system.

The lambda calculus consists entirely of functions of one parameter. In its pure form, these functions are unnamed, but for ease of understanding, they are often given names like `plus` and `equals`. Most<sup>[[citation needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citation_needed)]</sup> modern languages, including [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions), [C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator#lambda-operator), and [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), support these anonymous functions.

#### Length 1:

```
x
```

The variable x. A variable is the simplest example of a *lambda term*, or a valid lambda expression. Note that a variable need not have a type (in fact, **must** not in the untyped lambda calculus, as types do not exist [hence, untyped]).

#### Length 3:

```
f x
```

Application of the function `f` to the variable `x`. Note that function application is left-associative, though this can be overridden with use of parentheses.

#### Length 4:

```
λx.x
```

The identity function! This gives a first look at the form of functions. A lambda function consists of two parts: the parameter (the variable between the first `λ` [lowercase Greek letter lambda] and the first `.`), and the return value (everything after the first `.`). In this example, the parameter, `x`, is mapped to (guess) `x`, so the identity function returns whatever value it is fed, be it a number, a Boolean, or a lambda term.

This is an example of an inductive rule of lambda terms: if `t` is a lambda term and `x` is a variable, then `λx.t` is a lambda term. In this example, `t` is the lambda term `x`, so this rule makes `λx.x` a lambda term.

#### Length 4:

```
λx.y
```

A slightly less interesting example, this is a function of `x` that returns `y` regardless of `x`'s value. Feed it `5`? It gives `y`. Feed it `λx.y`? It gives `y`. Since y is a variable and therefore a lambda term, this expression is indeed a lambda term.

#### Length 5:

```
f x y
```

This is application of a [curried function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), the basis of the computational completeness of the lambda calculus. `f` is here called on `x`, returning `f(x)`, a function (this is called partial application—though `f` takes two parameters, one can create a new function by passing `f` only one). This new function is then applied to `y`. Because of the left-associativity of the lambda calculus, this is read as `(f(x))(y)` instead of `f(x(y))`.

An example of a use for this form: `f` maps `x` to a function that maps `y` to `x+y`. This is a change through currying of the basic addition function; instead of writing `plus(x, y)`, we write `plus(x)(y)`.

#### Length 7:

```
λx.λy.x
```

Finally, something interesting! This function of x returns not a value, but another function! The return value is `λy.x` (which is effectively identical to `λx.y` above), so this expression takes an argument `x` and returns the constant-value function that returns the given `x`.

This function has some interesting behavior in conjunction with certain others, very similar to that of the Boolean true.

#### Length 7:

```
λx.λy.y
```

Just like the previous example, but it returns the identity function rather than a constant-value one. As you will see soon, this can be made to behave like Boolean false.

This and the previous example are known as the [Church booleans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_Booleans).

#### Length 7:

```
λf.λx.x
```

This very closely resembles the Church false; in fact, it is identical, despite the f and x in place of x and y! Through a process called α-conversion, the lambda term `λx.R` can become the equivalent expression `λy.R'`, where `R'` is `R` with all instances of `x` replaced with `y`. This is intuitive enough—if `f(x)=2x` and `g(y)=2y`, then `f` and `g` are equivalent.

The different notation for this function and the Church false is to aid intuition. While the latter takes any two arguments and returns the second, this one is intended to take a function of a value (`f`) and a value (`x`). It then applies `f` to `x` **zero times** and returns the result.

With certain other convenient functions, this one can be treated as the number zero. This is an example of a [Church numeral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals).

#### Length 8:

```
(λx.x) y
```

Application of a function again, but this one actually does something, instead of merely serving as a template! The function `λx.x` is applied to the variable `y`, done by substituting `y` for `x` (the parameter) in the return value, `x`. This yields `y`, as one might expect from applying the identity function to `y`.

This process of replacing each instance of the parameter in the return value with the argument is called β-reduction.

#### Length 9:

```
λf.λx.f x
```

Ooh, something exciting! This looks like the Church numeral for zero, but with `f x` in place of `x`. Here, the function `f` is applied **once** to `x`, and this result is returned. We'll call this the Church numeral for one. Noticing a pattern? Yep, the Church numeral for `n` returns a function of `x` that returns `f` applied to `x` `n` times.

#### Length 14:

```
λa.λb.λf.f a b
```

This function pairs two values, `a` and `b`, creating a function that takes a function parameter `f` and returns `f` applied to `a`, applied to `b`. These pairs, known as Church pairs, will become very useful later on.

Of course, pairs would be useless without a way of retrieving their elements:

#### Length 12:

```
λp.p λx.λy.x
```

This takes as input a Church pair and returns the first of the pair. Suppose `p` is the pair `(a, b)`. By the definition of pairs, `p` applied to `λx.λy.x` (Church true) is equivalent to `λx.λy.x` applied to `a`, applied to `b`. This returns `a`.

#### Length 12:

```
λp.p λx.λy.y
```

Likewise, this function returns the second element of a pair. Confirmation of this is left as an exercise for the reader (hint: it's the same as that for the previous snippet).

#### Length 18:

```
λn.λf.λx.f (n f x)
```

Y'know what? Rather than adding a separate snippet for each natural number, why don't we include a recursive way of defining them? This is the successor function, one which takes as input a Church numeral and returns the next.

Here's an example: let's call this function on 1's Church numeral, `λf.λx.f x`. This gives us `(λn.λf.λx.f (n f x)) (λf.λx.f x)`, which is by α-conversion equivalent to `(λn.λf.λx.f (n f x)) (λg.λy.g y)` (this is done to avoid name collisions). β-reduction turns this into `λf.λx.f ((λg.λy.g y) f x)`.

Apply β-reduction once more, inside the parentheses, and we have `λf.λx.f ((λy.f y) x)`. Again! `λf.λx.f (f x)`... Ooh! This looks like what I would expect two's Church numeral to be! How nice.

Another look at the successor function reveals that it is quite intuitive: it takes a Church numeral `n` and returns another Church numeral, one that returns a function `f` applied to `n` applications of `f` to `x`—that is, `n+1` applications of `f` to `x`.

#### Length 30

```
λa.λb.a (λn.λf.λx.f (n f x)) b
```

Spamming successor functions gets tedious. Let's skip all that and define addition! This snippet takes two Church numerals `a` and `b` and returns their sum, as a Church numeral.

Of course, we must test this. Note that the outer parentheses contain the successor function exactly; since we already understand that one, let's just call it `SUCC` now. Our expression becomes `λa.λb.a SUCC b`.

Let's add two and three (defining `TWO` as `λf.λx.f (f x)` and `THREE` as `SUCC TWO`). `(λa.λb.a SUCC b) TWO THREE` is β-reduced to `(λb.TWO SUCC b) THREE` and again to `TWO SUCC THREE`. This does PRECISELY what we'd hoped—it applies succession to three two times, yielding two plus three!

Comment: By the way, Vote count no-longer restricts how many snippets you can write.

Comment: Ah, I missed that.

Answer (score 16):

### VB.net

**(0 Code Example)**

If you import the schema for a XML document, you'll get improved Intelli-sense support for the XML you are using. For example the rss schema.

```vb
Dim rss = XMLDocument.Load("path to rss")
Dim items = rss.<
```

At this point you'll see `<channel>`

```vb
Dim items = rss.<channel>.<
```

At this point you'll get

```vb
<title>
<link>
<description>
<language>
<pubDate>
<lastBuildDate>
<docs>
<generator>
<managingEditor>
<webMaster>
<item>
```

Let's continue.

```vb
Dim items = rss.<channel>.<item>
For Each item In items
  Dim title = item.<
```

At this point you'll get

```vb
<title>
<link>
<description>
<pubDate>
<guid>
```

Also it also works for xml node attributes. `node.@`

---

**1 Char**

`!` aka the Dictionary Lookup Literal can be used on dictionary retrieve the value of a key, the key used with the literal can not be a variable and thus changeable at runtime.

---

**2 Chars** (VB14 or later)

`?.` Null Propagation operator

Example usage.

```vb
Dim x As String
Dim c = x?.Length
```

is equivalent to the following code.

```vb
Dim x As String
Dim c As Nullable(of Integer)
If x Is Nothing Then
  c = New Nullable(Of Integer)()
Else
  c = New Nullable(of Integer)(x.Length)
End If
```

Comment: While you don't get an upvote you must first post a single factoid about your language of choice in plain english, no code yet :-)

Comment: @WillP The rules say the number of characters is upvotes plus downvotes, so (your?) downvote means he can delete the whole post and post a single character thing from the language.  That said, the factoid doesn't really have to do with the language anyway, rather with the program most use to write it (Visual Studio).

Comment: @Namfuak It's upvotes *minus* downvotes in the way you'd expect. If I said otherwise somewhere then that's a typo. I downvoted this since it does not follow the "no code in the factoid" rule. But it could be fixed or Adam can delete this answer and try again.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Huh, now I reread it and that's pretty obviously what it says.  Dunno how I misread it the first two times.

Comment: @WillP It describing VB.net Visual Studio IDE feature, not a feature of the programming language. The "code" is showing where the feature will available.

Comment: @Namfuak You have to use VB.net, to use in a programming language.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies I could delete the "code" but without know how and where this feature is enabled, you naturally wouldn't be aware of it.

Comment: My bad. I admit I just saw the code blocks and assumed it was true code. It does seem a little borderline but it's alright. I'd change my vote but it won't let me unless the answer is edited.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies I just edited it, so you should be able to undo your vote if you want.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies I like skirting the borderline, as it is at the fringes of the definitions.

Comment: `Nullable(of Integer)` is equivalent to `Integer?`, so you should just use that instead. Then you can say `c = Nothing` or `c = x.Length` depending on the `If` result. And are you going to update this answer at all? If not, I could continue, since I program in VB.NET.

Comment: Where is continuation?

Comment: @Qwertiy He hasn't been active since his last comment above. I could copy the data so far into a new answer and vote to delete this one? The answer barely gets started on VB.net, so I'd almost flag this as "not an answer".

Comment: @mbomb007, but it alreary has 15 upvotes...

Comment: @Qwertiy That's *why* it should be closed. Because the user obviously isn't updating it with new code. It's severely lacking in code to begin with. A new answer will get new upvotes.

Comment: @mbomb007, the other way is to ask moderator to mark answer as community. Then continue it.

Comment: @Qwertiy Yeah. That's probably better.

Answer (score 16):

## [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org)

Elixir is a functional, concurrent, general-purpose programming language built atop the Erlang Virtual Machine (BEAM). Elixir builds on top of Erlang to provide distributed, fault-tolerant, soft real-time, non-stop applications but also extends it to support metaprogramming with macros and polymorphism via protocols.

[Link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/44805/edit) for myself, or anyone who wants to contribute to this answer.

**Length 8**

```
fn-> end
```

This is an example on how to create a function, this function only returns `nil`, to call it, you must assign it to a variable, for example: `x=fn->123 end`, then call it using `.()`, such as: `x.()` that would return `123`.

**Length 7**

```
[a: 12]
```

This is example of creating keyword list (list of key-value pair), this statements are equal to `[{:a, 12}]`. We could access the value using square bracket and the key, for example:

```
kl = [a: 12, b: 13]
kl[:b] # 13
kl[:c] # nil
kl[:a] = 14        # error!
kl = [a: 14] ++ kl # [a: 14, a: 12, b: 13]
kl[:a] # 14
```

**Length 6**

```
<<65>>
```

This is an example on how to create a binary, this would result a valid string `"A"`, to concat the string or binary you can use `<>` operator, for example: `"AB" <> <<67,68>>` that would end as `ABCD`

**Length 5**

```
{1,2}
```

Tuple is just like a list, to get the length, use `tuple_size` function, to get the element on n-th position, use `elem` function, to change the value of n-th position, use `put_elem` function. To find more about the difference between lists and tuples, visit this [link](http://elixir-lang.org/getting_started/2.html#2.8-lists-or-tuples?).

```
x = {3,"yay"}
elem(x,1)
# "yay"
put_elem(x,1,"wow")
# {3,"wow"}
```

**Length 4**

```
[12]
```

This is an example on how to create a list, to get the length, use `length` function, to append with another list, use `++` operator, to remove all first element that exists in another list we could use `--` operator. To get the first and last element use `hd` and `tl` function. To get the n-th element, use `Enum.at`, to set, use `List.replace_at`.

```
[1, 2, 3] ++ [4, 5]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4] -- [2,3]
# [1, 1, 2, 4]
hd(list)
# 1
tl(list)
# 4
Enum.at(list,3)
# 4
List.replace_at(list, 0, 9)
# [9, 1, 2, 4]
```

**Length 3**

```
1/2
```

This is an example on how to do division, the result is `0.5`, to do integer division, use `div` function, for example `div(7,2)` or `div 7,2` would return `3`.

**Length 2**

```
?A
```

Question mark is one way to get the integer (or code-point) value out of a character, for this example it would return `65` as defined in the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding.

**Length 1**

```
1
```

This is the example of integer literal, to check whether a variable or literal is integer, we could use `is_integer` function. There are virtually no limit on how big an integer can be, since it uses [bignum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) as implementation. The limit on the VM in 32-bit platform is 536870911 bytes and 64-bit platform is 2305843009213693951 bytes, the integer creation will fail when the value are larger than those size or when not enough memory.

**Factoid**

[iex](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/iex/IEx.html) is Elixir's interactive shell ([REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)). To exit this program, press `Ctrl-C` twice.

Answer (score 16):

### **[Mathcad](http://www.ptc.com/products/mathcad/)**

Well, this is not my favourite language, but this definitely hasn't been covered here, and it looks like a great golfing lang to me!
To those blissed to not know what it is: Mathcad is sort of like a simplified Matlab, but clunkier. It has existed since 1986, and it is one of the oldest software products of its kind.

**Factoid:** Mathcad is a purely-procedural programming language with type inference and a really, really weird editor: each operator is added to the program by a keyboard key or combination of keys, but gets displayed on-screen as a (sometimes quite long) keyword.

Oh, and it doesn't support spaces, except in strings. And no tabs or linebreaks. Even if you have a very long line of code. Yes, Mathcad is weird.

**Length 1**

Here's a simple program in Mathcad:

`a`

This is a perfectly valid program. It declares a (global) variable `a`. Mathcad doesn't have any constants. And, since it uses type inference, this variable can become anything Mathcad can make it, from an integer to a matrix. Cool, huh?

Interesting fact: I call it a "variable", but, theoretically, Mathcad does not have any global variables, only *redefinable global constants* that can be *redefined* to have a new value, albeit only in global scope.

Another interesting fact: that thing is also a function. I'll explain it later. Just believe me for now.

And yes, this declaration is completely, totally useless. You can even say this causes problems as it limits the key shortcuts we can use if we decide to define it in another statement.

**Length 2**

Here's another simple valid program in Mathcad:

`a'` (equivalent to `'a`)

Formatted as `(a)`

What does this do? This takes our newly declared `a` into parentheses! This doesn't do anything really, but is still valid code, too. Parentheses in Mathcad are normally used in arithmetical expressions.

I hope you're beginning to see the sheer weirdness of Mathcad. An apostrophe as a shortcut for parentheses? Who could have ever guessed it? By the way, we will get the same thing if we just type in `(a)`. But be warned, if you haven't typed in an opening parentheses before `a` first, no closing one allowed! Why? No idea...

**Length 3**

Time for some *real* stuff! We can do (global) variable assignment now!
`a:1` (equivalent to `a=1` in this case)
Formatted as `a:=1`

We've assigned the value `1` to our "global variable", making its type a (signed, no unsigned types in Mathcad) integer. Or, speaking with Mathcad's terms, we "defined the global constant `a`". As `a` wasn't defined before, `=` maps to global variable assignment as well as `:` (this won't work if `a` has been already defined *or* simply declared). Funny thing: the type is limited to the range of... `[-999999999999999, 999999999999999]`. Although Mathcad "boasts" calculations on numbers with as long as 17 decimal places, in reality, it will work without error with 15-decimal-place integers maximum even with peak settings (at least on my copy of Mathcad 15). Why does it even count them by decimal places? I can only guess...

**Length 4**

Now, some functions!

`b(c)` (finally something formatted just as typed)

This is a valid piece of code that is actually a function declaration, something like a C function prototype. It declares a function `b` with one parameter, `c`. Note that you can't leave the parameter list between the parentheses empty.

Why? Well, the proper Mathcad syntaxis for a 'void'-parameter function is actually... to omit the parentheses. Yep, exactly the same as declaring a "global variable". In Mathcad, every "global variable" is sort of like a parameterless function that always returns one thing - the value it was initialized to by a definition or a redefinition. I'll demonstrate it later.

Oh yes, and functions can be redefined, just like variables. However, Mathcad has no overloading, so the function called will always be the last one declared. How very, *very* handy.

Funny thing about our little function declaration: it is just as useless as a "global variable" declaration. It won't allow us to call itself, it won't allow us to use it to call a function with the same signature that will be added later. It will just sit there and be 100% syntactically correct.

**Length 5**

Let's do something fun with our functions!

`c:b{1` (formatted as `c := b ← 1`)

Note that this definition raises a warning about redefining a built-in Mathcad unit. Yes, Mathcad is one of those languages that sport a standart library built in right into the language, just like PHP. `c` is internally defined as a "meters-per-second-speed-floating-point" type variable approximating the speed of light.

So what does our definition do? Nothing important, actually. It is a parameterless function that does one thing: define a local variable b, initialize it to 1, and return the result of the expression, which is also 1.

Actually, Mathcad has an explicit `return` operator, but it not always needed: Mathcad will return the last thing it sees in the function if it doesn't see the `return`. Period. Be it a value, a variable, or the result of an expression, it will be returned.

Another funny note: local function variables can have default values if a "constant" of the same name has been declared in the global scope. You can change the local variable's value, but you cannot change its global scope counterpart's value. So yeah, in that sense, Mathcad's "global variables" could be called "constants" (although I think that "weird crap" describes them much better than either of these). So, no shared function state. That's sad since Mathcad gives us no multithreading capabilities to compensate for that.

**Length 6**

Still not enough space for making a multi-expression function, so let's play with some ranges instead! Also, it's a good time to finally reach (numeric) evaluation.

`0,2;9=` (formatted as `0,2 .. 9 =` )

This is a standalone expression that defines a range from `0` to `9` inclusively with a `2 - 0 = 2` step.

The operator basically works like this: `range-start {optional: , range-start + range-step} ; range-end`

It is then *evaluated numerically* by the `=` operator. In Mathcad, "evaluate" = "output". In this case, it outputs a (vertical) table of all the elements of this range, which are, in this case: `0 2 4 6 8`.
If you remove `,2`, the step will default to `1`, giving you 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.

**Length 7**

Ah, finally, "linebreaks" in functions!

`a:b{1]2`

Formatted as:

[image]

This is a function that takes no parameters and returns... 2. This demonstrates two things: Mathcad's idiotic "line breaks" and its weird and almost completely useless "sequence-point subblock" construct.

Yes, my friends, this is what Mathcad gives us instead of line breaks. `]` means "add line after last value, symbol, block in parentheses or empty line". So, if you want to write an expression on one line and another expression on the next line, you have to *first* prepare a line for the second expression, and *then* write the first expression. Otherwise, the last part of your expression ends up in its own small "sequence-point" sub-block. This can be a terrible pain in the ass.

Why do I call it a "sequence-point subblock"? Because it is basically the same as the old **C** parentheses-and-commas sequence-point construct: `(expr1, expr2, ..., exprn)`. To those of you who do not know what this is: it evaluates all the comma-separated expressions in order and returns the last one. The subblock above does exactly the same: it evaluates the expressions on each line in order and gives out the result of the last one. Yes, this could theoretically be useful in structuring a function. Probably.

By the way, the "sequence-point subblock" can also be used in global context. Just type in a value/symbol/block in parentheses and hit `]`, then the next one, etc., and when you're done, hit `=` to get the last value. This can be useful in... um... oh, I give up, it's also totally useless.

**Length 8**

And here's how you get an expression per line in Mathcad:

`a:]b↑b{1` (from here on, I'll use the arrow symbols in place of the arrow keys).

Formatted as:

[image]

This is a parameterless function that assigns 1 to b and then returns it.

I think this needs a little explanation. First, we create our function with `a:`. Then, we add a new line to it with `]`. The cursor automatically travels to the added line, so we type `b` there, then use the up-arrow key to return to the previous line, and there initialize `b` to one.

Of course, this is golfed. In Mathcad, it is easier to add as much lines in advance as you might need, then move your cursor to the first one with the mouse and start typing your expressions, hitting the right-arrow key every time you need to go to the next line. `*insert facepalm here*`

Comment: Mathcad prepared against hidden whitespace programs.

Comment: Whilst I'm please that you have drawn attention to Mathcad, might I suggest that you become more familiar with Mathcad and edit your remarks accordingly?  Mathcad is much more capable, and easier to edit, than you suggest.  It does numeric computation using the IEEE 80-bit format (hence the 17 digits) but stores using the 64-bit format.  It also has an arbitrary numeric precision symbolic processor.   Look up Global Variables - they have a specific meaning in Mathcad.  For general use, Mathcad is my go-to maths application as it's a lot simpler to get stuff up and running (I also use Matlab).

Answer (score 16):

## LambdaMOO

LambdaMOO is a server for running an object-oriented [MUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD) which can be programmed live by the players themselves. The LambdaMOO server handles the telnet connection for each player, reading in what the player types, parsing it and running the correct verb. It also persists all of the objects to a database, meaning you can shut down a server and bring it back up and the environment will be exactly where you left it. (It's much like a smalltalk image  in this regard.)

The oldest running LambdaMOO server (up since 1991) is at [lambda.moo.mud.org](http://lambda.moo.mud.org/); you can telnet to port 8888 and log in as a guest to look around.

This answer will cover the LambdaMOO programming language (which has no separate name), but will of necessity touch upon other aspects of the LambdaMOO environment, such as the server, players and databases.

Some interesting links if you'd like to learn more:

- Wikipedia: [MOO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOO)
- Wikipedia: [MOO (programming language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOO_(programming_language))
- Wikipedia: [LambdaMOO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LambdaMOO)
- [LambdaMOO Programmer's Manual](http://www.moo-cows.com/docs/manuals/ProgrammersManual.html)
- [moo-cows.com](http://www.moo-cows.com/)

### Factoid

LambdaMOO code is stored as bytecode and decompiled for editing. The original intent was for it to be stored and edited offline, then uploaded to the server. In practice, it turned out to be easier to edit it live on the server, so a decompiler was implemented. The bytecode is expressive enough that this tends not to be an issue, and it has the advantage of enforcing a uniform coding style!

### Length 1

```
;
```

Like many languages, LambdaMOO statements are semicolon-terminated, and an empty statement is valid. However, it is optimised away by the compiler and won't be there when the program is edited again! (This same compiler optimization also cleans up empty else statements and the like.)

`;` is also used as a synonym for `eval` at the beginning a line of user input, allowing programmers to test code without writing an entire verb. (Normally, user input is interpreted as English-like commands such as `go west` or `take the box`.)

### Length 2

Because it is designed for programming an interactive environment, LambdaMOO objects are persistent and are identified by a unique number. They have two types of data associated with them, properties (data) and verbs (code). Both properties and data are inherited from an object's parents, and can be overridden.

Object numbers are represented as `#nnn..`, starting from 0 and counting up. The first LambdaMOO server (`lambda.moo.mud.org`) has been running since at least early 1991 and is up to `#124703`. It would be a lot further than that if they hadn't implemented object number reuse around 1996. Objects are not usually created and recycled automatically; instead, they are created by players to represent persistent "physical" objects--rooms, players, a wind-up duck, and so on. Because of the "Virtual Reality" design, even objects which wouldn't ordinarily be physical are generally represented as such on a MOO. For instance, the database of player's birthdays is "`a computerized datebook shaped like a big birthday cake.`"

There are two objects of particular interest to be found in every MOO database:

- `#0` is The System Object. It is the only positive object (negative ones will be covered under Length 3) which is treated specially by the server.

  - Various verbs of #0 are called by the server when events happen, such as a player typing a line, the server starting or stopping, and so on. It is the job of these verbs to handle the event as necessary; thus, the database (and the verbs of #0 defined therein) define most of the behavior of the actual server.
  - Properties of #0 are used for a special syntax for referring to objects globally, without memorizing their object number. If `#0` has a property named "`foo`" set to `#1234`, `$foo` can be used anywhere to refer to `#1234`.
- `#1` is the Root Class, the parent of all other objects.
  LambdaMOO (like JavaScript) uses [prototypal inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) rather than the more common class-based inheritance. Every object has a parent, from which it inherits any properties and verbs that are not defined on itself. (#1 is the parent of both itself and #0.) #1 defines a few verbs and properties which should exist on every object, such as a name and description, as well as various verbs to handle events such as: creation and recycling; moving things into and out of the object; moving the object into and out of other objects; and handling user input and output.

### Length 3

LambdaMOO uses negative object numbers to represent special things which do not actually exist, but which must have an object type so they can be manipulated in the same way as a normal object.

- `#-1` - `$nothing` - An object which is not. Most commonly seen in the context of object locations: all objects must have a location; objects which don't need to be inside of something else have their location set to `#-1`.
- `#-2` - `$ambiguous_match` - Used as a placeholder when the user's input could have matched multiple objects. For instance, "ball" in a room with a "red ball" and a "blue ball" will be represented as `#-2` (generally causing a "which did you mean?" error message).
- `#-3` - `$failed_match` - Used as a placeholder when the user's input couldn't be matched to any object. For instance, "ball" in a room which only contains a "red cube" and a "blue cube".  This generally causes an "I see no x here."-type message.
- `#-4` and below are used to represent players who have not logged in yet (that is, they're still at the login screen). These players need an object number so the code can interact with them, but can't be given a positive one because the server doesn't know who they are yet. When I log in, for instance, my connection might be given `#-6` until I log in, at which point the connection is re-associated with my actual player object, `#124434`.

### Length 4

`verb`, `dobj`, `iobj`: When the user types in a command, it is split up according to the form `verb [direct-object [preposition indirect-object]]`. (For example, `look`, `take ball`, `give ball to Henry`.)

`direct-object` and `indirect-object` are matched to an actual object (or `#-1` or `#-2` if necessary) and `verb` is called on whichever object is found to have a matching one first. (It searches the player, the room, the direct object, and the indirect object, in that order.) That verb can then use the special variable `verb` to find out what it was called as (equivalent to `$0` in a bash script), and `dobj` and `iobj` to determine the objects that were matched to the direct and indirect objects. There are also special variables for the preposition, as well as the actual strings (rather than matched objects) for the direct and indirect objects.

### Length 5

`1?2|3` - This is the syntax for the ternary conditional operator; in most c-type languages it would be `1?2:3` instead. There is no special type for binary values; rather, each possible value for each possible type is categorised as either true or false. True values are ints and floats other than `0` and non-empty strings and lists. Everything else is considered false, including `0`, `""`, `{}`, and all objects. Thus, `1?2|3` evaluates to `2`.

### Length 6

`player` is another special variable (like `dobj` et al), but it refers to the player object that executed the command. For instance, when I (#124434) type `pull lever on contraption`, the `contraption:pull` verb has the `player` variable set to #124434. This is most commonly used for output: the player has a `tell` verb which sends a line of text over the correct network connection to the person's computer, so they can read about the antics of the horde of lemmings they have just unleashed on an unsuspecting Barney.
(The Rube Goldberg Contraption has to be seen to be believed. Telnet to  lambda.moo.mud.org port 8888 and go southeast from the Living Room.)

### Length 7

```
"ab"[2]
```

Strings are represented with the usual double quotes, and list indexes are done with square brackets. Unlike many languages, lists and strings start indexing with 1 rather than 0. Thus, this expression returns `"b"`.

### Length 8

`#1:huh()` is the shortest verb call I could come up with. Verbs are the same as a method in most other languages; the syntax for calling them is `#nnn:verb([arguments...])`.

You wouldn't generally call `:huh()` directly; it is called by the default core when a player tries to do something to an object that the object doesn't support.
For instance, `globnitz ball` will look up `ball` (say it's #1234), discover that `#1234:globnitz` doesn't exist, and call `#1234:huh()` instead.
 The default implementation of `#1:huh` just tells the player `I don't understand that.`

### Length 10

```
create(#1)
```

The `create()` function call is used to create a new object. The argument is the parent object; `create()` then returns a new object which is a child of that object. (Some forks of the LambdaMOO server, such as [stunt](http://stunt.io), also support multiple inheritance. It works more or less as you would expect.)
Thus, this command creates a new object which inherits the properties and verbs of `#1`, described above.

Unlike most object-oriented programming languages, objects in LambdaMoo are not something you create very frequently. This is partly for technical reasons: there is generally a quota which limits the number of objects a player can own, to reduce database bloat. However, it is mostly because objects are very much a physical *thing* (inasmuch as anything can be physical in a virtual world). If you make an object, players can see it, pick it up and carry it around.

There are patches which you can apply to the LambdaMOO server to get something that resembles a traditional object; these are called "waifs" in LambdaMoo parlance. Waifs have properties and verbs but don't have object numbers, are automatically garbage-collected when they leave scope, and do not appear in the world. If you want to use these you will need to compile the server with the waif patches applied.

If your server has object recycling enabled, the object reference you get is not guaranteed to be unique: it may have been used by a different object in the past. When creating an object this is not an issue, since you have never heard of whatever it was before. However, you need to bear this in mind when using object numbers: `#1040` which used to be a vacuum cleaner may have been recycled into a tax form since you last used it. In practice, this is not usually a problem: just as you wouldn't throw out a perfectly good vacuum cleaner, you don't recycle a useful object. (I've found that you usually run into this problem only when you have a reference to something a different player owns, and that player is reaped: all of their objects get recycled.)

Answer (score 16):

## [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

### Factoid

> jq is like `sed` for JSON data – you can use it to slice and filter and map and transform structured data with the same ease that `sed`, `awk`, `grep` and friends let you play with text.

### Length 0

With an empty code `jq` just formats the JSON data. Often an essential first step when you need to process a huge .json file:

```
bash-4.3$ jq '' <<< '{"network":"StackExchange","site":["Programming Puzzles","Code Golf"]}'
{
  "network": "StackExchange",
  "site": [
    "Programming Puzzles",
    "Code Golf"
  ]
}
```

### Length 1

```
.
```

The `.` is the simplest filter, kind of neutral: just the unaltered input (kind of `cat`). But more important, is the way to refer the current value (kind of `$_`) in an expression:

```
bash-4.3$ jq '.*2' <<< '3.14 42 2015'
6.28
84
4030

bash-4.3$ jq -R '{(.+"-"+.):.}' <<< 'foo'
{
  "foo-foo": "foo"
}
```

### Length 2

```
[]
```

No, not those `[` and `]` which delimit an array literal in JavaScript, Ruby, PHP, … (Though that syntax is also valid in `jq`.) Here `[]` is more like Ruby's splat operator, which flattens an array:

```
bash-4.3$ jq '.|"\(.) Mississippi"' <<< '["one","two","three"]'
"[\"one\",\"two\",\"three\"] Mississippi"

bash-4.3$ jq '.[]|"\(.) Mississippi"' <<< '["one","two","three"]'
"one Mississippi"
"two Mississippi"
"three Mississippi"
```

The difference may be more clear if we use concatenation instead of interpolation:

```
bash-4.3$ jq '.+" Mississippi"' <<< '["one","two","three"]'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): array (["one","two...) and string (" Mississippi") cannot be added

bash-4.3$ jq '.[]+" Mississippi"' <<< '["one","two","three"]'
"one Mississippi"
"two Mississippi"
"three Mississippi"
```

### Length 3

```
add
```

No, not the plain old addition. That is the same `+` in `jq` too. `add` is a builtin function which adds all elements of an array:

```
bash-4.3$ jq 'add' <<< '[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,17,19]'
85
```

To solve [Gauss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss#Anecdotes)'s task of adding numbers between 1 and 100:

```
bash-4.3$ jq -n '[range(1;101)]|add'
5050
```

But as it is just repeated `+`, works for any data type for which `+` is defined, for example strings, which get concatenated:

```
bash-4.3$ jq 'add' <<< '["stack","over","flow"]'
"stackoverflow"
```

### Length 4

```
type
```

Just tells what type the data has:

```
bash-4.3$ jq 'type' <<< '3.14 "3.14" [3.14] {"pi":3.14}'
"number"
"string"
"array"
"object"
```

Of course, in most cases this will be used in some kind of condition when iterating over an array's elements. For example to find out which one is not numeric:

```
bash-4.3$ jq '.[]|select(type!="number")' <<< '[0,1,2,"cukoo´s egg",4,5]'
"cukoo´s egg"
```

### Length 5

```
empty
```

`null` means nothing, the absence of something.
`empty` means absolutely nothing, not even nothing.

```
bash-4.3$ jq '.[]|if.==2then null else. end' <<< '[1,2,3]'
1
null
3

bash-4.3$ jq '.[]|if.==2then empty else. end' <<< '[1,2,3]'
1
3
```

Answer (score 16):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt)

**Japt** is a shortened version of **Ja**vaScri**pt**, created by myself in early November 2015.

### Click on any snippet's header to try it in the [online interpreter!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt)

#### Factoid

Japt is heavily based off of JavaScript. After transpiling Japt's syntax features to JS, it is evaluated as vanilla JS. This allows easy building of an online interpreter.

#### [Length 1](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=0A==&input=)

```
Ð
```

Ah, the letter Eth. *(Don't tell anyone, but it's my personal favorite.)* This is the first example of one of Japt's defining features: **Unicode shortcuts**. Each one-byte character from `¡` to `Þ` has or will be assigned two or more chars to stand in for. `Ð` happens to stand for `new Date(`.

Another nifty feature is that **missing parentheses are automatically added**. This code transpiles to:

```
new Date()
```

Finally, **implicit output**: The last expression (separated by `;`) is automatically sent to the output box. On my computer, the output comes up like so:

```
Sun Nov 29 2015 09:37:30 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

One important thing to note is that in the interest of saving bytes, Japt replaces each close-paren with two close-parens, and each space with one. So instead of writing

```
Ð)+1
```

you would have to write

```
Ð +1
```

#### [Length 2](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VbI=&input=NQ==)

```
U²
```

Now we get to **implicit input**: `N` is pre-defined to the evaluated input. `U`, `V`, `W`, `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are set to the first six items. If there are less than six items in the input, the remaining vars are set to 0 instead.

Also, the Unicode shortcut `²` is set to `p2` . This means that the code is really `Up2`. All lower­case letters are reserved for **methods**, and are transpiled to e.g. `.a(`. This makes the code

```
U.p(2)
```

Japt has three main **data types**: strings, arrays, and numbers. And all three of these have different meanings for `.p()`. Here's what happens with the different input types:

- `string.p()` = `.repeat()`, so the input is repeated twice and outputted.
- `array.p()` = `.push()`, so `2` is added to the end of the array, and its new length is outputted.
- `number.p()` = `.pow()` (hence the shortcut being `²`), so the input is squared and outputted.

#### [Length 3](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VeZx&input=Wy0zLCAwLCAtNiwgNywgNCwgLTFd)

```
Uæq
```

One of Japt's main strengths is its large selection of **array manipulation functions**. There are many helpful functions that we could use on arrays; more than the 26 lowercase letters can hold. So to get around this limit, we can use the lowercase accented letters in the range `à-ÿ`. `æ` returns the first item in the array that returns truthily when run through a function.

Another strength is **auto-functions**: if a lowercase letter is given in place of a function, it transpiles to e.g. `function(c){return c.q()}`.

So, this code returns the first item whose `.q()` returns with a truthy value. But what is truthy? As it turns out, almost everything: the only values in JS that are not truthy are `""`, `0`, `NaN`, `null`, and `undefined`. And `q` is square root on numbers, which returns `NaN` for negatives and `0` for 0. So if the input is an array of numbers, this returns the first positive one:

```
-3   NaN    falsy
 0   0      falsy
-6   NaN    falsy
 7  ~2.646  truthy!
 4   2      truthy
-1   NaN    falsy
```

This example returns `7`. But what about non-numbers? `q` splits a string into chars, and joins an array, so the only falsy value that's not a number will be the empty array:

```
[]       ""         falsy
[1,2,3]  "123"      truthy!
""       []         truthy
"abc"    ['a,'b,'c] truthy
```

The `q` trick has many other applications, which we will look at later.

#### [Length 4](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=oVhjVg==&input=WyJhYmMiICJkIiAiZWYiXSAx)

```
¡XcV
```

Let's take a look at **functions** now. `¡` stands for `Um@`, and `@` stands for `XYZ{`, which is transpiled to `function(X,Y,Z){`. So here we have:

```
U.m(function(X,Y,Z){return X.c(V)})
```

This results in a whole tree of possible outputs, depending on the types of `U` and `V`:

- If `U` is a number, `m` is `Math.min` and returns `NaN`.
- If `U` is a string, `m` maps each char `X` to:
- If `V` is not specified or 0, `X`'s char code.
- Otherwise, `NaN`.
- If `U` is an array, `m` maps each item `X` to:
- If `X` is a number: `X`.
- If `X` is a string: if `V||0` is within the length of `X`, the char code at `V` in `X`; otherwise, `NaN`.
- If `X` is an array: `X` flattened (i.e. all items in sub-arrays are brought up to the base array).

#### [Length 5](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=YEjBTSE=&input=)

```
`HÁM!
```

Believe it or not, this doesn't give the user a ham. ;) On the contrary, it outputs a warm welcome:

```
Hello!
```

How does this work, you ask? Well, the secret lies in the backtick: Japt uses the [shoco library](http://ed-von-schleck.github.io/shoco/) for **string compression**. To compress text, you call `Oc` like so:

```
Oc"Hello!"
```

This will give you the compressed string. To decompress, you can do one of two things: 1) Use `Od"..."`, or 2) wrap the text in backticks. This is why Japt is shorter in the ["Hello, World!" challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63338/42545) than almost every other language that doesn't have a built-in for "Hello, World!".

Oh, and one more thing: If you have a quotation mark or backtick (or dollar sign, or curly bracket, or parenthesis, or any combination of the above) at the end of a program, you can leave it off, saving an extra 1 or more bytes.

#### [Length 6](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=Va6krHJe&input=WzAgMSAyIDMgNCA2IDggMTIgMTYgMjQgMzcgMTI3IDEwMjkwOF0=)

```
U®¤¬r^
```

Lots of Unicode shortcuts here: `®` stands for `m_`, and `_` stands for `Z{Z`. `¤` stands for `s2` , and `¬` stands for `q` . Putting this all together, we get:

```
UmZ{Zs2 q r^
```

If the input is an array of numbers, this maps each item `Z` to `Z.toString(2).split("")`. But what is that `r^` at the end? `array.r()` is the `reduce` function, which takes in a function of at least two parameters, and uses that function to combine each item with the previous value. As an example:

```
[0,1,2,3,4]rXY{X+Y
```

This reduces the array with addition. The result is 10; it works like this:

```
prev value: 0; next value: 1; result: 1
prev value: 1; next value: 2; result: 3
prev value: 3; next value: 3; result: 6
prev value: 6; next value: 4; result: 10.
```

But `^` is not a function, so what happens? Japt has a nice feature where if the first thing inside parentheses is an operator, it's transpiled to a function which takes in two arguments, and returns the result of the args being combined with that operator. So this whole program ends up as:

```
U.m(function(Z){return Z.s(2).q().r(function(a,b){return a^b})})
```

Which maps through each number, turns it to its an array of its binary digits, and finally returns `1` if this contains an odd number of `1`s, and `0` otherwise.

#### [Length 7](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VeAgbV9yIS0=&input=WzAgMSAyIDMgNCAxMDBd)

```
Uà ®r!-
```

More array manipulation: `à` returns all possible combinations of the array. You've already seen that `®` is a shortcut for `m_`, and that `r-` would reduce by subtraction. But what does `r!-` mean? The difference is simple: an operator preceded by `!` reverses the order of the resulting function's arguments. Here's exactly how this works:

```
Code  Transpiled
r-    .r(function(a,b){return a-b})
r!-   .r(function(a,b){return b-a})
```

After putting this all together, we end up with:

```
U.à().m(function(Z){return Z.r(function(a,b){return b-a})})
```

This takes all possible combinations of the input array, then reduces each by subtracting the previous result from the current item. For example, `[1 3 7]` becomes:

```
Comb.    Reduction       Result
1 3 7    3-1=2, 7-2=5    5
1 3      3-1=2           2
1 7      7-1=6           6
1        1=1             1
3 7      7-3=4           4
3        3=3             3
7        7=7             7
```

#### [Length 8](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VWas5Ssg5F4=&input=WzAsMSwyLC0xLC0yLDUsMiw3LDQ1LC0xNy41XQ==)

```
Uf¬å+ ä^
```

Hooray for array manipulation! `å` is a cumulative reduce (i.e. like `r`, but returns an array of each intermediate value), and `ä` maps each adjacent pair of items through the function. As shown before, `¬` becomes `q` , which performs square root on numbers. So if the input is an array of numbers, `fq`  filters out the non-positive ones, as shown in Snippet 3. Let's try it:

```
U   [1,2,-3,5,0,7]  [1,0,-1,1,1,0,1,1]
f¬  [1,2,5,7]       [1,1,1,1,1]
å+  [1,3,8,15]      [1,2,3,4,5]
ä^  [2,11,7]        [3,1,7,1]
```

`q` has even more potential in this area, which will be demonstrated in a future snippet. This program is obviously not super useful, but hey, messing around with math is fun. :)

#### [Length 9](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=K7Igxm4gLViy&input=NQ)

```
+² Æn -X²
```

Here I wanted to showcase one of the features which has the largest impact on the order of inputs: Auto-insertion (specifically of `U` in this case).

In some situations, attempting to use a method or operator when there is no value immediately to the left of it will cause the transpiler to insert a variable of its own instead of giving an error. In this snippet these three rules are used:

- At the start of a line, `U` will be inserted
- At the start of a function, `U` will be inserted
- At the right side of an operator, when the left side is a single variable, the same variable will be inserted

Thus this piece of code is identical to the snippet above after auto-insertions and without shortcuts:

```
U+Up2  oXYZ{Un -Xp2
^ ^         ^
| |         | Auto-inserted at the beginning of a function
| |
| | Auto-inserted because the left side is just "U"
|
| Auto-inserted at the beginning of a line
```

What the code does is compute the sum of U and U squared, and then for each value X in the range from 0 to that sum it outputs -U minus X squared. This exact snippet isn't particularly useful, but auto-insertion definitely can save a few bytes especially if you pick the right order of inputs.

Lots to come as I have time to add it!

Comment: Are you sure `[]` is falsy? Seems to be truthy on SpiderMonkey

Comment: @Downgoat You are correct. Apparently I was mistaken.

Comment: Can i has moar snippets? You are at 11.

Answer (score 16):

## Prolog

#### Factoid

Prolog is one of the first and most popular logic programming language.

Since Prolog is a declarative language based on first-order logic, programs in it can be surprisingly elegant, or devilishly mindbending.

> “In Prolog programming (in contrast, perhaps, to life in general) our goal is to fail as quickly as possible.” — *The Art of Prolog*

#### Length 1

```
X
```

In Prolog, any identifier that starts with an uppercase letter is a *variable*, which initially has no value. Unlike most programming languages, variables in Prolog can only take a value *once* (we say that the variable gets *unified* with something). After unification, a variable cannot be updated (unless backtracking occurs… more on that later). Variables only get a type once they are unified (the type of what they get unified with), therefore a *free* variable can be unified with anything.

#### Length 2

```
X.
```

This is a valid query in Prolog. Unlike most languages, in prolog you run queries (like in SQL), and the Prolog execution engine will attempt to satisfy that query. In particular, it will unify variables along the way if those unifications make the query true. Each query ends with a period.

Here however, the query is not really meaningful, since we are asking Prolog to check that a free variable `X` is true, and it is for an infinite number of different unifications (any integer for instance would make this true). Therefore, here is what SWI-Prolog answers to that query:

```
% ... 1,000,000 ............ 10,000,000 years later
% 
%       >> 42 << (last release gives the question)
```

#### Length 3

```
nl.
```

In Prolog, any identifier that starts with a lowercase letter is called an *atom*. They can be used to name predicates, facts, or simply as string-like objects. Here, `nl/0` is a predicate which has 0 arguments (hence the `/0` notation) and which is a built-in in Prolog. This predicate simply prints a line break to `STDOUT`:

```
?- nl.

true.
```

You can see that Prolog really likes to print `true.` when it manages to satisfy your query (or `false.` when it doesn't).

#### Length 4

```
X=0.
```

In Prolog, `=` is unification. Prolog will satisty this query by unifying `X` with `0`, which is the only possible way of satisfying it.

#### Length 5

```
X=[].
```

In Prolog, the list is a central data structure that you will use constantly. All lists are written in square brackets. A special list that will show up very often (particularly when writing your recursion termination condition) is the empty list, noted `[]`.

#### Length 6

```
X=3+B.
```

Prolog is homoiconic, and as such the above query is perfectly valid. The REPL returns the following:

```
X = 3+B.
```

In short, we are unifying variable `X` with the expression `3+B` (which does not get evaluated in any way). If we now unify `B` with something, this will be reflected in `X`:

```
?- X=3+B, B=5.
X = 3+5,
B = 5.
```

(As you can see, `X` is not evaluated to `8`)

#### Length 7

```
X*X#=4
```

Here I am cheating slightly. To make the above work, you must first run the following query: `use_module(library(clpfd)).`. This is the constraint logic programming in finite domains (CLPFD) library, which allows us to do very powerful things: for instance, the REPL will return the following for the above query:

```
X in -2\/2.
```

`\/` represents the union of two domains. Therefore, what Prolog is telling use here is that for `X` to satisfy `X*X = 4` (the `#` in the query is CLPFD's syntax for constraints), `X` must be either -2 or 2.

This is a very powerful mechanism that allows to write constraints on variables, without specifying how to find the values that satisfy them. Writing something like a sudoku solver with this library is thus extremely easy: you only have to describe the constraints between cells, and the starting clues. Prolog will then find solutions for you!

#### Length 8

```
X=2;X=9.
```

Prolog is a logic programming language, and as such you expect to be able to use disjunctions. This is exactly what `;` (*Or*) does: `X` unifies with `2` *OR* `X` unifies with `5`. When running this in Prolog's REPL, we get the following:

```
?- X=3;X=9.
X = 3
```

The REPL halts after printing you this answer, instead of finishing and waiting for a new query. Indeed, Prolog thinks there are other possible answers (and there is one in this case), and so it is waiting to see if you are interested in those. By pressing `;`, it will give you another answer:

```
?- X=3;X=9.
X = 3 ;
X = 9.
```

which is what we expected to get. Here, Prolog knows there are no other possible answers for what we queried, so it will finish and wait for another query.

The mechanism behind this is called *backtracking*: when Prolog choses to unify `X` with `2`, it remembers that it made that choice when in fact there are other possibilities (here, unifying `X` with `9`). When we ask for another answer (or if the query had failed after that choice), it will backtrack to the last choice it made and try another one, until no other choice is available.

#### Length 9

```
a(ax+b).
```

Here is a fact, that constitutes your source code. We can make some interesting queries on that fact, to check out Prolog's pattern matching mechanism (remember that identifiers starting with an uppercase letter are free variables):

```
?- a(X).
X = ax+b.
```

Cooler:

```
?- a(X+b).
X = ax.
```

Even cooler:

```
?- a(X+Y).
X = ax,
Y = b.
```

#### Length 12

```
length(L,3).
```

`length/2` is a built-in predicate of Prolog which is true if its first argument is a list of length its second argument. Here, we are setting the second argument as a ground integer, and the first as a variable. Thus, we get the following behavior:

```
?- length(L,3).
L = [_G1500, _G1503, _G1506].
```

That is, for that query to be true, `L` must be a list of 3 elements; those elements are `_G1500`, `_G1503` and `_G1506` which are variables (those names are internal variable names).

We can also run that predicate with both arguments as variables, and get the following very powerful behavior:

```
?- length(L,M).
L = [],
M = 0 ;
L = [_G1512],
M = 1 ;
L = [_G1512, _G1515],
M = 2 ;
L = [_G1512, _G1515, _G1518],
M = 3 ;
L = [_G1512, _G1515, _G1518, _G1521],
M = 4 ;
…
```

Comment: Length 7: That's not cheating. It's explained in the CLP(FD) library documentation that users are encouraged and even expected to have `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).` in ther initialization file, so that CLP(FD) constraints are avilable in *all* programs.

Answer (score 15):

### STATA

Factoid: STATA is a statistical language that is used mainly for economics modelling.

Length 1:

```
l
```

This lists all variables and every observation for each variable in a big table. It is shorthand for the list command and demonstrates that many commands can be shortened to save characters when golfing.

Length 2:

```
di
```

This is short for display, which can take any number of arguments separated by space and displays them to the console. With no arguments, it just prints a new line.

Length 3:

```
#d;
```

This is short for #delimit ; which changes the delimiter from a carriage return to a semicolon. In fact, anything but #d cr will change it to a semicolon.

Length 4:

```
so a
```

This command sorts the data in memory by variable a in ascending order.

Length 5:

```
cap "
```

The capture (shortenable to cap) command captures the errors that occur with other commands, including syntax errors. Here, the non-closed quote is an invalid command in STATA, but because capture is used, there is no error, and code can continue.

Length 6:

```
drop a
```

This command removes the variable a (and all values for a for observations in the dataset). In addition, drop can be used to specify a list of variables to drop or even a list of observations (with slightly different syntax).

Length 7:

```
l ///
a
```

Like in many languages, STATA allows comments with //. However, adding an extra / will cause the command to continue onto the next line, so here, this is equivalent to l a, which will list each observation's value for the variable a.

Comment: Epidemiologists and survey statisticians also seem to love Stata. I haven't had much exposure to it so I'm excited to see where you go with this.

Answer (score 15):

## MUMPS

#### Factiod

MUMPS, or M or Cache, was a programming language created at the Massachusetts General Hospital. In fact, that's where the name come from. No, it doesn't come from an infectious disease. The name is an acronym--**M**assachusetts General Hospital **U**tility **M**ulti-**P**rogramming **S**ystem.

One interesting piece about MUMPS is that there is no restriction on language specific keywords. Couple this with the fact that whitespace is somewhat important and you can easily make some big goofs in code.

#### 1 Character

```
Q
```

In MUMPS, it is possible to shorten most keywords down to a single letter. For instance, the `Q` command is short for `quit` and will terminate the program.

#### 2 Characters

```
$H
```

`$H` will help you get the current time. This command returns the number of days since 31-DEC-1840 followed by a comma, followed by the number of seconds since midnight. So, calling `$H` at 5pm on 13-MAR-2015 would return `633624,61200`

#### 3 Characters

```
N Q
```

Now, this will be interesting. At first glance, you would recognize the `Q` command from before. However, this is where MUMPS can break, easily. The `N` command is short for `new` and is used to initialize variables. Since all data in MUMPS is technically strings, no data types are needed. However, there are no reserved keywords, so we now have a variable called `Q`.

#### 4 Characters

```
W @Q
```

Now life is getting even more interesting. Let's set up the environment a little. First, you need to know that `W` is short for `write`. Think `print` and you're good. So, we have some variables defined as below:

```
N Q,A
S Q="A"
S A="B"
```

Now, if we take the line above in our example, what do we write out? At first thought, maybe the answer is `A`. That would be wrong. The answer is `B`. That's because the `@` symbol is used for indirection, which allows you to reference variables by the name stored in a different variable. This is similar to reflection.

#### 5 Characters

```
2+3*9
```

Now, in any *normal* programming language, the expression above would evaluate to `29`. However, MUMPS is strictly **left-to-right**. This means that the expression above would evaluate to `45`. Liberal use of parentheses is recommended.

Comment: Why does `$H` return the number of days from Dec 31, 1840? Is there something special about that date?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Legend has it that when Mass General was in the process of creating MUMPS, they wanted to be sure that their date system would encompass all the dates they might ever need to enter. In surveying their medical records (on paper at the time), they found that the oldest date they had on file was the birthdate of a (since-deceased) patient who was born in 1841. And so, it was decided that the MUMPS epoch would start on Jan 1, 1841.

Answer (score 15):

## Element

This is a language that I invented in early 2012 to be a simple golfing language. By this, I mean that there is very little to no operator overloading. The operators are also simpler and fewer in number (all single characters) than most modern golfing languages.

**You can find the current version of the Element interpreter, written in Perl, right [here](https://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element).**

The most interesting features of this language are its data structures. There are *two* stacks and a hash that are used to store information.  One stack is used mainly for arithmetic, while the other is used mainly for logic.  The hash is used to store "variables."  The use of a hash means that the number of variables can be practically unbounded.

---

### Length 1 Snippet

```
#
```

The `#` operator removes and destroys a single item from the top of the main stack (the m-stack or arithmetic stack).  When standing alone, this doesn't do anything at all.

---

### Length 2 Snippet

```
_`
```

This is a "cat" program, or a program that outputs its input.  The `_` operator gets a line from STDIN and puts it on the main stack.  The `` ` `` operator (a backtick) removes the top item from the main stack and prints it to STDOUT.

---

### Length 3 Snippet

```
!{}
```

This program is an infinite loop.  The `!` is a logical NOT. The control stack starts empty, logically equivalent to "false," so we must invert it and put a 1 on it.  The `{}` form a while loop. It repeats as long as the top value of the control stack is true (non-zero and non-empty-string).  Since the control stack will always have a 1 on top, this repeats forever.

---

### Length 4 Snippet

```
_2^`
```

This is a program that squares the input and prints the result.  The `^` is a operator which performs exponentiation.  Since this is stack-based, the 2 must be pushed on the stack before the ^ is performed.  The `^` is just one of the many basic arithmetic operations possible, such as addition or modulo.  All arithmetic takes place on the main stack.

---

### Length 5 Snippet

```
_'[_]
```

This code reads a line with a number as input and then reads that number of additional lines.  This can useful in some golf challenges.

The square brackets form a FOR block, which also doubles to serve as the language's IF block.  FOR blocks look at the top value on the control stack and repeat the code inside that number of times.  The first line of input is transferred to the control stack with `'`.  Element can be rather heavy with the apostrophes/quotation marks/backticks sometimes.

---

### Length 7 Snippet

```
_,1+,#`
```

This takes a character from input and outputs the character with the character code 1 greater than that.  It's like a ROT1 cipher without the rotation.  The `,` is the char<->code operator, which pushes both the number and code value for its input.  The first occurrence is used to convert to a number, of the second output is used.  IN the second occurrence, the number is discarded with `#` and the character is outputed.

---

### Length 12 Snippet

```
1_'[3:~2@+]`
```

This prints the Nth Fibonacci number.  New commands here are `:`, `~`, and `@`.  The `:` operator creates copies of the top item on the main stack.  It's top argument, the 3 in this example, determines the number of copies.  So, `0:` is the same as `#`, `1:` is a co=op, `2:` makes one additional copy for a total of 2, etc.

The `~` is variable reading.  Given a string (which can also be a number) as an argument, it returns the value that was previously stored in that variable. In this example, we are reading from a variable (the number we just made copies of) that we never stored anything in.  This gives the empty string, which serves as one argument for the next operator.  If we simply replaced `~` with `0`, then we would have to insert a space between the `0` and the `2`.

The `@` is stack manipulation.  Element only has one operator for rearranging the order of stuff within the stack (as opposed to moving things between stacks, which are `'` and `"`).  The first (bottom) argument of `@` is the source index, and the second argument is the destination index.  In this program, the arguments are 0 (represented by the empty string) and 2, so this operator consumes those numbers, and then moves the 1st thing in the stack to be the 3rd thing in the stack.

```
1                  push a 1
 _'                take input then move it to the control stack
   [      ]        FOR loop
   [3:    ]        make two additional copies of the top number (3 is the total count)
   [  ~   ]        turn one copy into a zero
   [   2@ ]        move from position 0 to position 2, behind the old number
   [     +]        add the old and newer number
           `       output the result
```

Comment: Update please..

Answer (score 15):

## Microscript

Microscript is a <s>new expiremental</s> golfing language I've been working on <s>recently</s>. For my *Death By Shock Probe* challenge, I was able to write a program that would have beaten out the leading Pyth entry by one byte, except for the fact that the language is too new to be eligible to actually compete in that challenge.

It uses a pair of stacks to manipulate data, and currently has just over 30 distinct commands

The esolangs wiki article can be found [here](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Microscript)

**Length 0 snippet:**

The empty program prints 0, followed by a newline. This is because the main register is initially 0, and printing is implicit unless otherwise specified.

**Length 1 snippet:** `p`

Prints the contents of the register to the output, followed by a newline. On end of execution, this will be done automatically, unless execution was halted by the `h` command.

**Length 2 snippet:** `99`

Any positive integer literal not part of another command will increment the main register by that value. Thus, unless part of another command, this will add 99 to the value in said register.

**Length 3 snippet:** `is*`

Currently the shortest example program on the esolangs wiki article. Takes in an input and squares it. `i` takes a number from the input and writes it to the register, `s` pushes it to the stack (unlike in HSPAL, this does not zero the register), and `*` pops it off the stack again and multiplies it by the value in the register, writing the result to the register. Then, as mentioned above, the new value is printed implicitly.

**Length 4 snippet:** `isi+`

Another example program from the esolangs wiki article. Takes two inputs and outputs their sum.

**Length 5 snippet:** `'~Pph`

`'<any character>` is the language's equivalent of a character literal. `P` prints as a character while `p` prints as an integer. Finally, `h` halts immediately without the implicit printing. Therefore, the output from this is `~126`. This is technically equivalent to the shorter (3 byte) `'~P`.

**Length 6 Snippet:** `i{z1p}`

This is a [truth machine](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Truth-machine) which converts values not in {0,1} to 1. The closing bracket is optional in this case, but I already had a length 5 snippet. `{}` is the equivelent of BrainF***'s `[]`; Microscript uses square brackets for other purposes.

**Length 7 Snippet:** `20ec1r4`

Simulates the rolling of 1,048,576 four-sided dice. This is what would have been the winning entry for my afformentioned *Death By Shock Probe* challenge had Microscript come out a short time earlier. The `c` command was the language's first form of iteration- essentially "zero the register, then repeat the following a number of times equalling the value that was in the register before it was zeroed". `1` increments by 1, and `r4` increments by a random integer on [0,4). Lastly, `e` is a base-2 exponential function while `E` is the base-10 equivalent. Thus, `10Ec1r4` (or, equivalently, `1EEc1r4`) would simulate the rolling of *ten billion* four-sided dice. Eventually.

**Length 9 snippet:** `1{I[h]fan`

A `cat` program that terminates on the first empty line (as the language currently lacks EOF detection)

**Length 11 snippet:** `0"Caxq"Caxq`

A reverse quine, and it's even one byte shorter than the one in the esolang article

**Length 13 snippet:** `ic1s]z1{[ph]*`

Calculates the factorial of a number given as input. Limited by the language's 64-bit integer type.

Answer (score 15):

### gs2

#### Factoid

gs2 is my own little golf language that has [the highest average score across submissions of all languages on shinh's golf site](http://golf.shinh.org/lranking.rb). It uses all 256 bytes, so it's like a cross between CJam and machine code. It's not perfect, but sometimes it's [really](http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?eight+hundred), [really](http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?Print+line+number+prefix) [good](http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?parity+of+numbers).

> **Note**: I'll encode all of the programs in [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), as if they were printed on a DOS computer, because I don't know of any better character set that assigns a symbol to all 255 bytes. (Even this one lacks a glyph for `FF`. Oh well.) To the right of each snippet, you'll find a hex dump.

#### Length 1

```
f                          66
```

I wanted to one-up [goruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64124/257418)'s 1-byte `Hello, world!`, so... This prints `"1\n2\nFizz\n4\nBuzz\n..."`. :)

#### Length 2

```
ï≡                         8B F0
```

`8B` is Python's `islower()` function, but it also works on bytes. `__ F0` is a 1-byte-block filter (it goes all the way up to `__ __ __ __ __ __ F5`). Thus, this program extracts all of the lowercase characters from STDIN.

#### Length 3

```
0▓B                        30 B2 42
```

If the first byte of a program is `30`, it's in **line mode** -- sort of like Perl/Ruby's flags. The remainder of the program, `B2 42`, will get mapped over each line of input.

`B2` is called `counter`, and the first time you push it, it's `1`, the second time it's `2`, etc. There's no way to reset it or anything. Dead simple.

`42` is swap, which will put the counter *before* the lines we're looping over. Thus this will perform a very lazy kind of line numbering:

```
abc          1abc
defgh   ->   2defgh
gs2!         3gs2!
```

Answer (score 15):

## Motorola MC14500B Machine Code

---

#### Factoid

Patented in 1977 by [Motorola, Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola), the [Motorola MC14500B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_MC14500B) is a CMOS processor in a 16-pin package. It has a 2-way data conductor (pin 3), and has 16 four-bit opcodes.

---

#### Length 1

Hexadecimal:

```
1
```

Binary:

```
0001
```

**Explanation**

```
1    Load data from the I/O pin to the register
```

With this 4-bit opcode, the register's value becomes the input value received by the I/O pin.

---

#### Length 2

Hexadecimal:

```
18
```

Binary:

```
0001 1000
```

**Explanation**

```
1    Load data from the I/O pin to the register
8    Output the register's value to the I/O pin
```

This single-byte operation, takes an input value via the I/O pin, and outputs via the same pin. Essentially, it is a `cat` program.

---

#### Length 3

Hexadecimal:

```
18F
```

Binary:

```
0001 1000 1111
```

**Explanation**

```
1    Load data from the I/O pin to the register
8    Output the register's value to the I/O pin
F    Jump back to the first opcode of the program
```

This will loop, taking an input and outputting its value. I used this snippet to demonstrate an infinite loop.

---

#### Length 4

Hexadecimal:

```
178F
```

Binary:

```
0001 0111 1000 1100
```

**Explanation**

```
1    Load data from the I/O pin to the register
7    If the register value is equal to the I/O pin's value, set the register to 1
8    Output the register's value to the I/O pin
F    Jump back to the first opcode of the program
```

This snippet will take an input, and output it's complement. This will continue in an infinite loop.

---

#### Length 5

Hexadecimal:

```
578EF
```

Binary:

```
0101 0111 1000 1110 1111
```

**Explanation**

```
5    Logical OR on the register and I/O pin
7    If the register value is equal to the I/O value, set the register to 1
8    Output the register's value to the I/O pin
E    Skip the next opcode if the register's value is 0
F    Jump back to the first opcode of the program
```

This snippet will take an input (essentially `"Do you want me to stop looping?"`). If the input is a `0`, it will loop infinitely, but if the input is a `1`, it will not loop.

If the input is `1`, it will output `0` (for `"not looping"`) and terminate, but if the input is `0`, it will infinitely output `1`.

Answer (score 15):

### PowerShell

#### Length 15 Snippet

```
(1,0,'E')[$x%2]
```

It is a very short way to output truthy/falsey values if you are asked to determine if `$x` is even. (or `E` for error)

It golfs down a `switch` statement

```
switch($x%2){0{1}1{0}2{'E'}}
```

It can index the array using modulo. So the basic algorithm is:

- If `$x` is even, then `$x%2` is `0`, so first element in array is `1`
- If `$x` is odd, then `$x%2` is `1`, so first element in array is `0`
- Otherwise if `$x%2` errors, it shows `E`

Same trick can be applied to output `1` (Truthy value) for odd number.

---

#### Length 14 Snippet

```
$a|% t*y|%{$_}
```

This combines several snippets below into a very powerful feature. Still using `%` as an alias for `foreach-object`, we use both of its position-0 positional parameters: `-memberName` which takes a string and will return the specified member for each object and can take wildcards provided they resolve to a non-ambiguous name (`String`'s `toCharArray` in this example); and `-process` which applies a script-block to each object (`{$_}` in the example).

The example above is a way to iterate through each character in a string and implicitly output it.

---

#### Length 13 Snippet

```
1,1|select -u
```

Parameters in PowerShell can both be *positional* and *expanded*. Positional meaning if the parameter flag isn't explicitly specified, it can be inferred. For example, `Get-Random 10` is the same as `Get-Random -Maximum 10`, because the `-Maximum` parameter is positional.

Here, we're using the expandable property of parameters. Since `-Unique` is the only parameter to `Select-Object` that starts with `-u`, we don't need to spell out the entirety of the parameter. Both of these features saves tons of bytes.

The output of this snippet, which feeds an `[int]`-array into the `Select-Object` cmdlet is `1`, as an `[int]`.

---

#### Length 12 Snippet

```
0xff*2KB-2e6
```

PowerShell has some <s>weird</s> special operators that allow large numbers to be written in small number of characters.

The `0x` unary operator converts characters from hexadecimal to decimal. For example, `0xff --> 255` or `0xbeef --> 48879`.

The `KB` (and `MB`, `GB`, `TB`, and 'PB') unary operators take input on the left and multiply it by `1024`, `1048576`, `1073741824`, `1099511627776`, or `1125899906842624`, respectively. For example, instead of `[int]::MaxValue`, or `2147483647`, you can write `2GB-1`.

The `e` (exponentiation) binary operator basically takes the input on the left and tacks on (the input on the right) number of zeros. For example, `2e6 --> 2000000`.

The output of this snippet as written is `-1477760`.

---

#### Length 11 Snippet

```
$a=($b=1)+1
```

In PowerShell, it's very important to remember that you're dealing with objects on a pipeline. This can be manipulated in several ways, and the above shows the concept of encapsulation. Commands placed in parentheses are executed first (as you'd expect), but the *output* of the command is left on the pipeline to be picked up later. Here, we're assigning `$b` to be `1`, and then assigning `$a` to be `$b+1`. This snippet is equivalent to `$b=1;$a=$b+1`, and shows an easy way to golf bytes anytime you're doing an assignment.

The implications here go beyond just that, however, since it's the PowerShell pipeline and so we're dealing with objects. This means that complex object creations can have nested function or procedure calls, for example calling a constructor and immediately calling a method on the resultant object, and then immediately calling a property on the result. Something like `(((New-Object foo).bar()).GetBaz()).baz` is perfectly legitimate. In some cases, you don't even need to assign the object to a variable.

Additionally, since anything left on the pipeline is implicitly printed after execution, this means you can accumulate data on the pipeline and print for essentially free. For an easy example, a simple accumulator from 1 to 10 (prints `1`, then `3`, then `6` ...) can be `1..10|%{($a+=$_)}` vs `1..10|%{$a+=$_;$a}`, saving a byte, but can save significantly more in other situations. Since we're talking about output, this is a good time to bring up that nearly every output to the console/shell in PowerShell includes a newline (technically `\r\n` because it's Windows), so if the challenge requires separators we get that for free, too.

---

#### Length 10 Snippet

```
$a,$b=1..9
```

PowerShell has the capability to do multiple assignment. In the above snippet, `$a` will be `1`, an int, while `$b` will be `(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`, an int-array. This has the ability to save lots of bytes if you're looking for particular items -- for example, `$a,$b=-split$somestring` will split `$somestring` on whitespace, store the first word in `$a` and the rest in `$b`. Very useful if you're looping through a string, for example, or re-manipulating the rest of the string in some fashion.

---

#### Length 9 Snippet

```
(4,9)[$a]
```

PowerShell has very loose type casting. *Very* loose. We can thus abuse this typecasting to transform array-indexing (as the above) into an `if`/`else` statement. For this snippet, if `$a` will somehow evaluate to a truthy value (a non-zero number, a non-empty string, any other non-`$null` variable, etc.), the Boolean result will be typecast to a `1` and so the `9` will be selected. Conversely, if `$a` evaluates falsey, the `4` will be selected. This is PowerShell's `x?y:z` style ternary if, and is significantly shorter than the equivalent `if($a){9}else{4}`. It's rare for an actual `if`/`else` statement to show up in PowerShell golfing.

---

#### Length 8 Snippet

```
$c+=++$i
```

A simple example showing a couple basic operations. PowerShell has both pre- and post- increment and decrement operators (`++` and `--`), and they function pretty much like you'd expect, *except* when it comes to uninitialized variables. Running the above snippet in a brand-new shell will result in `++$i` evaluating first as `$null + 1 = 1` and storing in `$i`, then adding that result to `$c` (also `$null`), which makes `$c` equal to `1` as well. Flip the pre-increment to be a post-increment and you get a different result, with `$c = 0` and `$i = 1`, *but* with `$c` cast as an `Int32`. This null-arithmetic is a sneaky way of shaving a couple bytes here or there, especially when it comes to not needing to check if a variable already is initialized.

---

#### Length 7 Snippet

```
,'a'*$b
```

Yeah, so that's a thing. No, really. It's the PowerShell *comma operator* and it's used to create arrays. As an inline (binary) operator, it creates multi-element arrays, as in `$myArray = 1,2,3`. As a unary operator, it creates an array with one member, as in `$myArray = ,1`. In both instances `$myArray.GetType()` will tell us that it's a `System.Array` object. Here, we're coupling this with operator overloading (multiplication, specifically) to create an array of length `$b` with each element equal to `'a'` -- that is, we can create and pre-populate an array in one go. It's important to note that the array element is evaluated *once* and then multiplied, so you *can't* do something fancy like `$a=1;$b=5;,($a++)*$b` and expect an array `1,2,3,4,5`. Bummer.

---

#### Length 6 Snippet

```
$a-gt2
```

OK, pretty simplistic, but this is a continuation of the below concepts. In addition to the usual `+-*/` operator overloading, PowerShell [*comparison* operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) (`-le -eq -gt` etc.) are overloaded, too. As are most other "basic" operators.

Let's suppose that `$a=3`, an int. Then, the above snippet will result in `$TRUE` as it's comparing "is 3 greater than 2?" So far, so standard. However, let's take `$a=(0,1,2,3,4,5)` an array of int's from 0 to 5. In this case, the above snippet will result in an array `(3,4,5)` - that is, it constructed a new array and populated it with all elements of `$a` that are individually greater than `2`. Have a constructed array already and want to know how many elements are equal to 0? Try `($a-eq0).Count`. Want the biggest element in the array that's smaller than a certain value? How about `($a-lt4|sort)[-1]` (using our "last element" trick from Snippet 4).

This sort of operator overloading continues to other objects, too, not just arrays and ints. `$StringA -gt $StringB` will categorize the two strings alphabetically. `$CharA -gt $CharB` calculates based on their ASCII value. And on and on and on. Pretty much any object in PowerShell can be compared like this.

As a bonus, in most cases, if the right-hand operand can be parsed appropriately, you can mix and match types like you can with normal arithmetic operators. As an example, `$DateA -lt "2015/12/17"` will implicitly parse the right-hand string into a .NET `datetime` object to calculate comparison.

Combined, the Length 5 and Length 6 snippets allow PowerShell codegolf answers to be *very* loose with type-casting, which cuts out a tremendous amount of bytes.

---

#### Length 5 Snippet

```
$a+$b
```

"What, really? The *plus-sign* is what you're showcasing? Phaw!" OK, OK, put down your torches and pitchforks, and hear me out. I'm showcasing operator overloading. "Well, so what, plenty of other languages have that! Plus, you showed that for your Length-1 Snippet!" Yeah, but that needs to also be coupled with PowerShell's powerful implicit casting and implicit parsing.

Operations like the above snippet in PowerShell take on the characteristics of the left-hand side operand. Suppose `$a='123'` and `$b=4`, with the first as a string and the second as an int. With the above snippet, the result will be `1234` as a string. Flip the order `$b+$a` and PowerShell will implicitly parse the string object to turn it into an int, and the result will be `127` as an int.

While this is powerful, and allows you to abuse plenty of different operators for nefarious codegolf purposes, it has the <s>quirk</s> feature that operators are not commutative. In other words, `($a+$b) -eq ($b+$a)` will return `False` in *lots* of cases.

---

#### Length 4 Snippet

```
[-1]
```

A secret weapon used when indexing arrays or strings or the like to retrieve "the last element." We don't even need to know the length of the array. Want the second-to-last element? Use `[-2]` instead. And so on.

One example where this comes in handy is in finding the maximal of a list of numbers. Suppose we previously stored them in `$x`. PowerShell already has an alias for `Sort-Object` as `sort`, thus, we can do `($x|sort)[-1]` to pull out the maximal item from `$x`, and we don't even care or know how many items are in `$x`, and it's significantly shorter than the "regular" method of `($x|measure -maximum).Maximum`.

---

#### Length 3 Snippet

```
iex
```

The command `iex` is an alias for `Invoke-Expresssion`, and is similar to an `eval()` style statement. However, it has implications for codegolf in that it can take parameters *or* pipeline input (because remember, the pipeline hands off objects, not text).

As a simple example, suppose I need to sum the numbers from 1 to 10. I could write `1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10`, but at 20 bytes that's pretty lengthy. I know I can get a range of numbers using the `..` range operator, such as `1..10`, but now I essentially have an array of integers. I can concatenate them together with the `join` operator, like so `1..10-join'+'`, and now I have a string that can be fed into `iex` as `1..10-join'+'|iex`, for 17 bytes. This simple example shows how very complex commands can be dynamically constructed rather than hardcoded, but still be executed as if they were coded directly, and can significantly cut down on byte-count.

---

#### Length 2 Snippet

```
$_
```

This was already introduced below in the Length-1 snippet, but it's important enough to reiterate here. Another strong suit that gives PowerShell advantages in codegolfing is the concept of *automatic variables*. That is, variables that are implicitly created in the background by the system. Here, the `$_` variable stands for "the current object in the pipeline." Essentially, it's a variable that is a dynamic placeholder for whatever object we're currently manipulating.

In the example loop `1..1e4|%{$_%5}`, the `$_` variable first holds the integer `1`, then `2`, then `3`, etc. The power is more evident when dealing with a collection of different objects - `$_` could be a string, an int, a custom PSObject holding the entire Windows System Event Log, a TCP/IP socket object, etc., all dynamically typed as the situation changes.

---

#### Length 1 Snippet

```
%
```

The other answer used a pipe `|` for the Length-1 snippet, and that's probably the most important 1-symbol snippet for 99% of use cases, but the `%` is functionally way more powerful for codegolf purposes, and introduces two important concepts.

The first is one of PowerShell's hidden codegolf weapons, aliasing, which significantly cuts down code length. Here, the `%` character is a standard alias for `ForEach-Object`, and allows us to create loops with very little code overhead.

The second is operator overloading. In PowerShell, as in other languages, the `%` operator stands for modulo -- `3%2` will return `1` as an example. However, thanks to a strongly/weakly typed system (more on that later), and strong syntax requirements, the same character serves double-duty.

For example, `1..1e4|%{$_%5}` is a loop that will generate and output a `123401234012340...` string that's 10,000 characters long (with newlines in between, more on that later).

I've already rambled [at length](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62295/42963) about the differences between `ForEach` and `ForEach-Object`, so I won't redo that here.

---

#### Factoid

Windows PowerShell had its origins over a dozen years ago (and actually just had its 9-year release anniversary; the original release was 14/Nov/2006) as Monad and the Microsoft Shell. I highly recommend reading the [Monad Manifesto](https://web.archive.org/web/20151023032759/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/powershell/archive/2007/03/19/monad-manifesto-the-origin-of-windows-powershell.aspx), originally published in *August of 2002*, for an amazing insight into the development process and reasoning behind naming conventions and features that developed to make PowerShell what it is today.

**Bonus Factoid** -- Even from the very beginning, there was [pushback](https://web.archive.org/web/20150515011054/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/25/583344.aspx) from hardcore users regarding the name change from *Monad* to *PowerShell*, including some pundits calling it a fad that would never catch on.

Answer (score 15):

## Jolf

## 0-vote

Factoid: Jolf is my personal utility language, and is sometimes suited for golfing; it was created mainly out of frustration trying to learn Pyth.

## 1-vote

```
τ
```

Jolf is encoded in ISO-8859-7, the Greek encoding. Not only is this one character, but it is also one byte. This stands for `2*pi`, or the literal constant *tau*. [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=z4Q)

## 2-vote

```
~ (there is a trailing space)
```

The tilde is one of the many extender functions in Jolf that allow for 2-byte sequences of characters. In this case, `~` is the ISO-8859-7 encoding. [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=fiA)

## 3-vote

```
ͺπt
```

This simply reads "pair pi and ten"; `ͺ` being the function that wraps two elements in an array, `π` being pi, and `t` being ten. (Also, Jolf has implicit output and that's good for stuff.) [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=zbrPgHQ)

## 4-vote

```
Ξhi!
```

Jolf is hostile. It does not like being talked to. Therefore, it says "ATTACKING  " when prompted. Just kidding, this is actually Jolf's string compression in action. In this case. it's using it's dictionary. [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=zp5oaSE)

## 5-vote

```
»HΒM!
```

This is Jolf's string compression in action. This output's the string "Hello!". Jolf uses shoco for compression/decompression. [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=wrtIzpJNIQ)

## 6-vote

```
ΣdQH1j
```

This is the first complex program here! `Σ` is function summation that accepts a function, a minimum, and a maximum. In this case, the function is `dQH`. `d` begins a single-arity function with arguments `H`, `S`, and `n`. `H` is the only argument we are concerned with for the moment. In this case, it is the number being acted upon. `QH` squares `H`, and `j` is the input. So, from `1` to the input, we count the sum of the squares. (If we were golfing, we could move the square function into a lambda as this: `ΣλQ1j`.) [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=zqNkUUgxag&input=MTAKCjUKCjEwMA)

### 7-vote

```
mΦx0/9t
```

This is another one of Jolf's builtins: Fibonacci with custom seeds. In this case, we take input (`x`) and perform the Fibonacci sequence with `Φ(0) = 0` and `Φ(1) = 9/10`, and that `Φ(n+2) = Φ(n+1) + Φ(n)`. [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=bc6meDAvOXQ&input=NQ), or [see the first 16 results in the sequence](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=Us6cczB-NWRSfi5Ibc6mSDAvOXQnOlM).

### 8-vote

```
₯S₯C+'0q
```

This is a sort of "growing" quine. `₯` is the document package, and this is what it looks like explained:

```
₯S₯C+'0q
₯S        set the value of
  ₯C      the code
    +'0   to "0" +
       q  the source code
```

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=4oKvU-KCr0MrJzBx)

### 9-vote

```
U+ΏQm4HXΏ
```

This is the distance formula for two array inputs! `Ώ` defines a function `Ώ` which can later be used.

```
U+ΏQm4HXΏ
   Qm4H    square the asum of H (e.g. if H = [a,b] m4H = a-b)
  Ώ        a function Ώ does this
       X   initially called with eval'd input
 +      Ώ  added to Ώ(x) (implicit input)
U          square root
```

### 10-vote

```
ΜzάdySHHHH
```

[Try this one here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=zpx6zqxkeVNISEhI)

I'm calling this the "be quiet, [jrich](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42844/jrich)!" program. It outputs this, using Jolf's turtle:

[image: jrich is quiet]

This looks a lot like jrich's avatar. This is how it works:

```
ΜzάdySHHHH
Μzάd        map 1 .. 16 over this function
    yS      create a square
      HH    at (H, H)  ; the index
        HH  of dimensions H x H
```

### 11-vote

```
"Hello, %!"
```

This greats the user, using string interpolation (`%`) and implicit input.

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=IkhlbGxvLCAlISI&input=IkRhdmlkIg)

### 12-vote

```
ps"afaik:lol
```

This outputs `as far as i know:laughing out loud`. Apparently, Jolf likes to text. Oh well.

### 13-vote

```
~jd=ΏmΓChHHΏS
```

This takes input (implicitly). It finds all pairs of integers below the input `x` that satisfy the condition of being before a number having the same collatz sequence length. Explanation:

```
~jd=ΏmΓChHHΏS
~jd            all pairs satisfying condition (think "~jenerate")
    ΏmΓChH     define a function Ώ that heads H and finds its collatz sequence length
          H    call Ώ on H (outer H)
   =       ΏS  call Ώ on S and see if its = to (^)
```

This is a demonstration of the concept, rather than a helpful one. Here's one that gives more clear results and filters self equal arrays:

```
ψh~jd=ΏmΓChHHΏSxd~!=FHgH
```

Can be golfed, but eh.

Answer (score 15):

## [Cheddar](https://github.com/vihanb/Cheddar)

[image]

Cheddar is a high-level, functional + object-oriented programming language designed to make programming easier, faster, and more intuitive.

---

Due to the fact Cheddar is still in development, running Cheddar programs can be rather difficult. [Ping me in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte), @Downgoat, and I'll help you test this stuff out.

---

### Factoid

Despite Cheddar's tasty name, it is **not edible**, if you'd like to eat Cheddar, please go to your local grocery store, not the Github.

---

### Length 1 Snippet

```
1
```

This is a number. You probably guessed that but Cheddar's numbers also have some cool features:

```
0b1011  // Binary number
0o1337  // Octal number
0xFFFF  // Hexadecimal number

123_456_789 // One hundred twenty three million, four hundred thousand...
1.333333333 // Decimal number (yes this is a regular old floating point)
```

### Length 2 Snippet

```
[]
""
''
```

These all create iterables. The first is an array `[]`. The second and third are strings. In Cheddar strings may have literal newlines in them.

### Length 3 snippet

```
|>9
```

This creates a range from 0 - 9, it is represented as an array so you can iterate over it, reverse it. Do anything you want!

Additionally you can use binary `|>` to generate a range from [a, b]

```
 0|>4
```

the above generates: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

### Length 4 Snippet

```
true
```

This creates a boolean with a value of `true`. This isn't very interesting, unfortunately.

### Length 5 Snippet

```
1?2:3
```

This is the ternary operator. This is the same as the following:

```
if (1) { 2 } else { 3 }
```

The difference is the ternary is an expression so rather than doing:

```
var a: String
if (goat.type == saanen) {
    a = "bleeeeeet"
} else {
    a = "baaaaaa";
}
```

You can do:

```
var a: String = goat.type == saanen ? "bleeeeeet" : "baaaaaa"
```

### Length 6 Snippet

```
(a)->a
```

This, obfuscated looking code is actually very simple. It defines a lambda, or anonymous function taking one argument, a, and returns it. Note the parenthesis are optional, the following is just as valid:

```
a->a
```

Now, if you were to call foo, it would return the value passed:

```
print foo(123) // prints `123`
```

#### Length 7 Snippet

```
var a=1
```

This is the shortest assignment in Cheddar.

Additionally other ways of declaring variables

```
const foo = bar        // constant
const foo: String = bar // Same but requires `bar` to be a specific type
var foo = bar       // Can be changed, so can the type
var foo: String = bar // Can be changed but only to another string
```

#### Length 9 Snippet

```
String::9
```

This shows a cool feature of Cheddar's called **casting**. Classes each have defined behavior for when any class (in this case Number), is cast to them. This would output `"9"`;

In this example String's Number cast is called which in turn casts to a string. You an also swap this around to do a number cast:

```
Number::"9"
```

which would output a number `9`.

In the event a cast fails, Cheddar throws an error. I'm planning on adding an operator `castable` which checks if a certain value (LHS) can be cast into (RHS). Which would work like:

```
if foo castable Number
    print Number::foo
```

Answer (score 15):

## Maple

#### Length 15

```
type(1,posint);
```

[Type checking](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=type) is an important aspect of input handling for procedures and commands.

```
> type(1,posint);
  true
```

#### Length 14

```
plot3d(cos(x))
```

[3D plots](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plot3d) are very useful for visualizing mathematical surfaces.
[image]

#### Length 13

```
Matrix(10,10)
```

or

```
<<1,2>|<3,4>>
```

Matrices are one of Maple's fundamental data structures. It is possible to perform many common operations, including numerous operations in Linear Algebra on matrices. There are several calling sequences for making a new Matrix. Above are two of the most common:
The [Matrix](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Matrix) command generates a new Matrix with r rows and c columns:

```
Matrix(r,c);
```

The shorthand notation < > can also be used to input a matrix.

```
<<1,2>|<3,4>>;
```

[image: 2x2 Matrix]

#### Length 12

```
f:=x->2*x+12
```

A [function](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=function) can represent a function call, or application of a function or procedure to arguments. In the example above, a new function called 'f' is created that takes an argument 'x', and returns 2 times the argument plus 12.

```
> f:=x->2*x+12;
> f(4);
  20
```

#### Length 11

```
assume(x>0)
```

The [assume](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=assume) routine sets variable properties and makes it possible to set relationships between variables. A common use is shown in the example above: the assume routine declares that a variable 'x' is a positive real constant. Applying such an assumption makes it possible for Maple to simplify expressions such as:

```
simplify( sqrt( x^2 ) )
```

Which returns 'x' only after an assumption is placed on the variable 'x'.

#### Length 10

```
D[1](f)(x)
```

The [D](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=D) command serves different purposes. It is primarily a differentiation command, similar to one of Maple's most used commands, [diff](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=diff), but it is also more general in two ways: it can represent derivatives evaluated at a point and can differentiate procedures.

#### Length 9

```
exp(I*Pi)
```

Euler's identity states that exp(I*Pi) + 1 = 0. In Maple's 1-D code, this is 9 characters long, however using 2-D Math notation, this can be displayed using 3 characters (4 if you count the space needed for the implicit multiplication of I and Pi):[image: Euler 2-D Math]

#### Length 8

```
plot(Ci)
```

This is the first entry that uses one of the most important parts of Maple: [plotting](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=worksheet/reference/PlottingGuide). Even though it is possible to construct a plot with less characters, i.e. plot(), this example gives a much more interesting result: the plot of the Cosine Integral.

[image: Cosine Integral]

This certainly isn't the last time you'll see a plot in this list as there are many more interesting expressions and plot variants in Maple. Some other interesting 8-character plots include:
Sine Integral:

```
plot(Si)
```

Exponential Integral:

```
plot(Ei)
```

Natural Logarithm:

```
plot(ln)
```

#### Length 7

```
cos(Pi)
```

When evaluating symbolic expressions, Maple returns results in an exact symbolic form. This means that the results are not approximated to any number of digits, rather the result is the exact value for the result. This is also what is known as having results with "infinite precision"!

```
> cos(Pi);
  -1
> evalf[5]( cos(Pi) );
  -1.
> cos(Pi/4);
  sqrt(2)/2
> evalf[5]( cos(Pi/4) );
  .70710
```

#### Length 6

```
rand()
```

The [rand](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=rand) command returns a random integer sampled uniformly from the range 0 to 10^12−1. Maple can also sample from numerous other statistical distributions.

```
> rand();
  395718860534
```

#### Length 5

```
1.*Pi
1.0*π
```

Maple supports arbitrary precision arithmetic. For example, here's Pi to 314 digits:

```
> evalf[314](Pi);
  3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659334461284756482337867831652712019091456485669234603486104543266482133936072602491412737245870066063
```

#### Length 4

```
999!
```

Maple can work with very large integers. The [Factorial](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=factorial) operator computes factorials for given values. The number of digits of `999!` is:

```
> length(999!);
  2565
```

#### Length 3

```
x$5
```

The `$` operator can be used to create a [sequence](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=$) for a given expression. For example,

```
> x$5
  x, x, x, x, x
> i^2$(i=1..3)
  1, 4, 9
```

#### Length 2

```
x:
```

Using the [colon](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=worksheet/managing/supoutput) operator suppresses output for entered commands.

#### Length 1

```
∞
```

Maple is a symbolic computation engine, so you can use the infinity character in computations for integrals, limits, etc. Also, results from symbolic computations can be considered to have "infinite" precision since Maple doesn't approximate purely symbolic results (see Length 7 example).

#### Factoid:

Maple is a mathematical programming language and computation environment. However, the name “Maple” is not an acronym for Mathematical Programming Language, it’s a reference to its Canadian heritage.

Answer (score 15):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony)

Images created with Timwi's tools with link provided in the Factoid!
The headers [Length n Snippet](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/) are Try It Online! links :)

#### [Length 5 Snippet](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=PzwhQDw&input=MSAx) - One of the [Logic Gates](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83209/59806)

```
?<!@<
```

This is the AND gate, from one of the [16 Logic Gates answer by Martin Ender♦](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83209/59806). In his answer, the explanation was left for readers as practise. Well, maybe it's time for the solution:

[image: and1]

First `?` reads the first input.

If it is `0`, then the IP got reflected to NE direction at `<` and directly wraps "to the left" (as it is `<=0`) and got printed at `!`.  Whatever it reads at `?`, it wraps and stops at `@`.

[image: and2]

If it is `1`, the IP takes the right branch for the "conditional" and hit the "inclined mirror" side of `<` and got reflected back and hit the "hub" side of `<` which sends it to W direction to read another input. It then wraps and hit the "horizontal mirror" side of `<` and gets itself to an implicit-if at the corner. **6** instructions made within this blue path.

*The different usages of `<` are all demostrated in this example*.

If the second input is `0`, then the IP goes along the red path above, which prints a `0` and reads the "third" input and stops.

If it is a `1` instead, yay we finally got 2 `1`s for the AND gate! The IP goes along the green path and prints out the `1` and terminates!

#### [Length 3](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=PCxAOw&input=SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ) and [Length 4 Snippets](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=PCxAOw&input=SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ) - Cats

These 2 are simplified (thus not a very good version) of a `cat` program. For a real working one, please see [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62306).

```
,;~
```

This reads and prints and also outputs a lot of trailing mysterious symbols.  What's happening?

`,` reads a byte and `;` prints it no matter what `,` gets (If there is no input, `,` will return a `-1` and `;` will print it modulo 256 which is `255`).

Here is a trick which is useful in creating Hexagons: Using `~` (negation) to control the direction the IP goes before it reaches an `if` (no matter it is an implicit one or an explicit one like `<` and `>` and some other conditionals).

If you find this hard to understand, then it's worth mentioning that this is *not* a linear loop.  As an exercise imagine the above are put into a 2-hexagon and you'll see why we need `~` to do make a loop with the implicit if :P The code basically runs in the same manner as in the length 2 snippet below!

Thus, when there is a byte, the memory will be positive and `~` makes it negative so it goes back to the top to read another byte.  Yet it won't stop...

So let's see the length 4 version of the `cat`.

```
<,@;
```

When you [try](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=PCxAOw&input=SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ) this, it looks good.  Finally we have one program which stops!

[image: cat4]

It starts on the top left with an initial value of `0`. A trick here which is (again) quite common - deflect the initial IP with `<`.  This is particularly useful when the main loop should end when the calculated value is `<=0`.

Here it comes to the blue path. `;` prints the null byte (as it is initially `0`) and `,` reads a byte. An implicit-if decides if it should go to the green one (doing nothing and wraps back to the main blue loop for printing this byte) or it should go to the red terminal `@`.

In some code golf challenges, it is acceptable to have null bytes printed before the desired output.  However this is not the case for the simple cat challenge attached above :P  Also, this does not handle null bytes `\0` well.  If you are curious how to do the `cat` with 6 bytes which handles `\0` and prints nothing else and stops, [check it out](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62306)! (The 6 bytes solution is shown after the 7 bytes)

#### [Length 2 Snippet](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=ISg&input=)

*This won't end.* Print all non-negative integers separated by `-`.

```
!(
```

Not really. Indeed this is printing the unintialized edge as number (`0`), then decrement it and print again without a separator (`-1`, `-2`, ...)

This is an illustration of both the Implicit Loop (wrapping) and Implicit If.

The IP starts at `!`, goes to the right to `(` and wraps to... not (directly to) `!` but somewhere else first. Because the code is used to fill in the smallest possible hexagon that can hold it:

[image: showcase_2]

(Blue) For the existing code, after IP runs `(` (decrements) and the memory edge becomes `-1`, it wraps to the middle row and goes all its way to the corner.

And, as its value is `<=0`, it goes to the left, which is the top row and we hit `!` again which prints `-1` and so on...

(Red) And if you change the source code to `!)`, it won't print `01234...`.  Because when it hits the corner, the memory edge is `>0` and it turns to the right option (Pun not intended) which is the lower edge, and the lower edge wraps back to the middle - however all the ops are no-ops so the IP can never escape from the loop.

#### [Length 1 Snippet](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=Og&input=)

```
:
```

If you try it, it ends soon and nothing will happen. Well 1 byte snippet in Hexagony can't do much.

`:` is the division in Hexagony and the result is rounded towards `-infty`.

Why introduce this? Lemme introduce the Memory Model of this one.  *Without loss of generality* (it sounds good using Maths phrases), this is the initial Memory Pointer:

[image: memory_model]

Like Instruction Pointers which has an Op which it's currently on (a position) and a direction, the MP also has an edge (which holds a value) and a direction.

The edge on its left is its Left Neighbor (L) and that on right is the Right Neighbor (R).

Like `+`, `-`, `*`, and `%` (Modulo), `:` is also calculating `L (operation) R`.

One "interesting" thing about `:` and `%` is that when the Right Neighbor is `0` (the default value of an uninitialized edge), it silently errors out and hence terminating the program.  This behaviour sometimes saves bytes when the termination `@` is not used to stop the program.

---

I have read the answer here which is nice :P I also found some interesting snippets on this site thus I would like to try to get a chance to post them. *I love Hexagons!*

### Factoid

Hexagony, as its name suggests, gives programmers a painful experience (agony) playing with Hexagons, with its Instruction Pointers (IP) and Memory Pointers (MP).  Great thanks to [Timwi](https://github.com/Timwi) who created [Esoteric IDE](https://github.com/Timwi/EsotericIDE) for debugging Esoteric Languages and [Hexagony Colorer](https://github.com/Timwi/HexagonyColorer) which helps explaining the coupled IP paths.

When an IP goes out of the Hexagon, it wraps (Yup, implicitly looping) as if the Hexagon is used for tiling the ground. (Not exactly the case, because if you really wanna connect all wrapping paths, you would end up their edge overlapped like the graph on the right)
[image: Wrapping]
`c1234` wraps to `567890` wraps back to `c1234`...
`abcd` wraps to `efgh` and goes on... and we hit a corner.

For corner cases, there will be an Implicit-If, with `<=0` is left and `>0` is right. Say you (the instruction pointer when you are programming) go all the way `efgh.3.` to the corner. You are facing East.  You would either wrap to the top which is on your *left* and the bottom which is on your *right*.  If the MP is pointing to a memory edge which is `<=0` you goes to the top, otherwise you goes to the bottom.

True beauty lies in making use of the implicit features and fitting different parts of the algorithm into Great Hexagonal Unity, with the use of mirrors (always like playing with scientific puzzle solving game).

Comment: Very nice diagram to explain the wrapping behaviour! :)

Answer (score 14):

#### HAML (HTML Abstraction Markup Language

> #### Factoid
>
> Haml (HTML abstraction markup language) is based on one primary principle: markup should be beautiful. It’s not just beauty for beauty’s sake either; Haml accelerates and simplifies template creation down to veritable haiku.

I'm partly doing this because I'm interested to see how many votes this could get around half a year after the original post ;)

#### Length 1 Snippet

```
%
```

`%` is the tag marker for Haml. So if for example `%div` was used, it would result in `<div></div>`

#### Length 2 Snippet

```
%a
```

As said above, `%` is the tag marker for Haml. So the `a` following the tag would tell Haml that it needs to create a set of tags with a inside like this: `<a></a>`. The `<a>` tag defines a hyperlink, which links pages and/or objects together.

#### Length 3 Snippet

```
%td
```

As above, this would form the tags for a table cell - `<td></td>`. Table Cells need to be prefaced by: 1) a Table tag `<table>`, 2) The Table Body (this is optional) `<tbody>`, 3) a Table Row `<tr>`. You would end up with something like this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>[Content Here]</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Length 4 Snippet

```
.a I
```

As `<div>` tags are so common, you can leave them off in `Haml`. The `.` here indicates that the text that follows will be the `CSS Class` to apply, then the text after that is placed inside the div. So the above would be:

```
<div class="a">I</div>
```

#### Length 5 snippet

```
.a#bc
```

A `.` defines the `CSS Class` - as above - but the new feature here is the `#`. This defines the `CSS ID` of the element. So the above would equal:

```
<div class="a" id="bc"></div>
```

#### Length 6 Snippet

```
.a Hi!
```

The second snippet that actually shows something!

Any plain text that comes after a class or id etc is the content for the tag. So the above code would result in:

```
<div class="a">Hi!</div>
```

#### Length 7 Snippet

```
%ul %li
```

Lists! The above is an unordered list (`%ul`) and then the list items are each specified as `%li`. So for the above to show something, we could do the following.

```
%ul %li Number one! %li And Two!
```

This would result in:

```
<ul>
    <li>Number One!</li>
    <li>And Two!</li>
</ul>
```

#### Length 8 Snippet

```
%p.a#b c
```

A paragraph! As before, the `%` indicates a HTML tag, so the above would be:

```
<p class="a" id="b">c</p>
```

A saving of 17 characters - 68% reduction :)

#### Length 9 Snippet

```
#a .b.c D
```

A `.` is the prefix for a css class, and to join two classes together, simply put the two classes without a space like above - `.b.c`. So the above equals

```
<div id="a">
  <div class="b c">
    D
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Length 10 Snippet

```
:style=>""
```

To insert custom CSS to an element in html, you would generally use `style="<!-- css here -->"`. The Haml variant is as above. You would use it as below:

```
%p{:style => "color: #fff;"} A Paragraph
```

Converted to HTML is becomes

```
<p style="color: #fff;">A Paragraph</p>
```

Comment: I doubt that HAML [classifies as a programming language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073/8478) by PPCG standards.

Answer (score 14):

## [ArnoldC](https://lhartikk.github.io/ArnoldC/)

**Factoid:**

ArnoldC, a programming language based on Arnold Schwarzenegger's one-liners, was created to "[to discover new meanings from the Arnold movies with the means of computer science.](https://github.com/lhartikk/ArnoldC#motivation)"

**Length 1 snippet:**

`1`

Just like many other languages, [ArnoldC considers 1 to be true and 0 to be false](https://github.com/lhartikk/ArnoldC/wiki/ArnoldC#logical-operations).

**Length 2 snippet:**

`""`

Two quotation marks are used to make a String.

**Length 5 snippet:**

`CHILL`

Chill ends a while loop.

**Length 6 snippet:**

`I LIED`

The Arnold quote ["I LIED" is equivalent to the value 0](https://github.com/lhartikk/ArnoldC/wiki/ArnoldC#declaring-variables)

GET UP is the addition operator.

**Length 7 snippet:**

`declaim`

The -declaim flag can be passed to the compiler to produce an audio file from the source code.

**Length 8 snippet:**

`BULLSHIT`

An else statement to be placed after an if statement.

**Length 9 snippet:**

`GET UP 33`

GET UP is the addition operator in ArnoldC, so the above code snippet can increment an integer by 33.

**Length 10 snippet:**

`ENOUGH TALK`

ENOUGH TALK is placed after GET TO THE CHOPPER to end the assignment of a variable.

Comment: ENOUGH TALK, DO IT NOW: `GET UP`!

Comment: *Passes through an abandoned answer only to discover it has got 7 total votes with only a "Length 1" snippet.*

Answer (score 14):

### [Minkolang](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang)

#### Length 6 snippet ([try it](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%24n%24*N%2E&input=5%206%200%2E1%20-3%20%281%2B1j%29%20%281-1j%29))

```
$n$*N.
```

This multiplies together the numbers in the input. `$n` reads in all of the numbers from input, `$*` multiplies together the whole stack, `N` outputs as a number, and `.` stops. The linked example has `5 6 0.1 -3 (1+1j) (1-1j)` as the input and `(-18+0j)` as the output, thus proving that Minkolang can handle integers, floats, and complex numbers.

It's also worth noting that Minkolang disregards non-numeric characters. In [this example](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%24n%24*N%2E&input=This5Shows6That0%2E1non-numeric-3characters%281%2B1j%29are%281-1j%29disregarded1.), the input is `This5Shows6That0.1non-numeric-3characters(1+1j)are(1-1j)disregarded1.` and the output is the same as before.

#### Length 5 snippet ([try it](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=od%3F%2EO&input=Hello%20world!))

```
od?.O
```

`cat` program. `o` reads in a character from input and pushes its ASCII code onto the stack (`0` if the input is empty). `d` then duplicates the top of stack (the character that was just read in). `?` is a conditional trampoline, which jumps the next instruction of the top of stack is not 0. If the input was empty, then the `.` is *not* jumped and the program halts. Otherwise, `O` outputs the top of stack as a character.

Here is a 5-byte solution to *reverse* cat ([try it](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%24o%24O%2E&input=Hello%20world!)):

```
$o$O.
```

`$o` reads in the whole input as characters, `$O` outputs the whole stack as characters, and `.` halts.

#### Length 4 snippet ([try it](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=V%20%20%2E))

```
V  .
```

Minkolang's spaceship can be *boosted* across empty space, which is done with `V`. This enables it to get to the `.`, where the program halts.

#### Length 3 snippet ([try it](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=3%40%2E))

```
3@.
```

This demonstrates the unconditional n-trampoline, `@` (its cousins are `! ? &`). Minkolang's codebox is toroidal, meaning that when the spaceship goes off any edge, it reappears on the opposite edge. Here, `3@` skips the next three instructions in the direction of travel, namely `.3@`, in that order. So it lands directly on the `.`, which stops the program.

#### Length 2 snippet ([try it](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=N%2E))

```
N.
```

This is the shortest program producing output (and stopping). `N` pops the top of stack and outputs it as an integer and `.` stops execution. When the stack is empty, any operation that tries to pop from the stack will pop a 0 as it has a bottomless well of 0s. Thus, `N` will output `0`  (with a trailing space) and then stop.

#### Length 1 snippet ([try it](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%20))

```
<empty space>
```

The shortest infinite loop in Minkolang. But this one has a catch. Unlike Befunge or ><>, this one loops through **time**. In fact, any column of empty spaces is a potential infinite loop.

#### Factoid

Minkolang is a Minkowskian (2+1)D stack-based semi-golfing language. The "Minkowskian (2+1)D" part simply means that there are two dimensions of space and one of time. The spaceship (or *program counter*, if you prefer) travels through time when it's not traveling through space. This might sound weird, but consider this: you are barely moving, sitting in your chair. Even if you include the motions imparted by the Earth's rotation, the Earth's journey around the Sun, and the Sun's journey around the Milky Way, it's still only a tiny fraction of the speed of light. So you move through time at almost exactly the rate of one second per second. If, however, you are moving through space at the speed of light, then *time stops*. Likewise, the spaceship in Minkolang moves through time when it can, when it's not moving through space! Any instruction that does not change its direction preserves it, and wherever there is a space that the spaceship is not boosted across, it starts moving through time (represented as the layers of the program).

Answer (score 14):

## Whitespace

**Factoid:**
It allows Whitespace programs to be hidden in the source code of programs in languages like C.

**Length 1**

```
[LF]
```

A single line feed. This is an *Instruction Modification Parameter* (IMP), which is the first token to determine which category of commands the code will be executing from. Line Feed corresponds to **Flow Control**.

**Length 2**

```
[space][space]
```

The `[space]` IMP corresponds to **Stack Manipulation**. Two spaces inserts the rest of the line of spaces and tabs encoded as binary onto the stack.

**Length 3**

```
[LF][LF][LF]
```

Once again, `[LF]` corresponds to Flow Control. Three line feeds in a row terminates the program.

**Length 4**

```
[tab][LF][space][space]
```

`[tab][LF]` corresponds to **I/O**. This command outputs the character corresponding to the value at the top of the stack.

**Length 5**

```
[space][space][space][tab][LF]
```

Pushes the number `1` onto the stack. This is an example of how numbers are defined for commands such as the Length 2 snippet: the first bit is the sign bit, with `[space]` being positive and `[tab]` negative, then for the rest of the line, `[space]` is `0` and `[tab]` is `1`.

**Length 6**

```
[LF][space][space][tab][tab][LF]
```

`[LF][space][space]` is a command to mark a label for jumping/subroutines later, and the rest of the line is encoded as binary as mentioned above. This one defines the label `-1`.

**Length 7**

```
[LF][tab][space][space][tab][space][LF]
```

`[LF][tab][space]` is jump-if-zero. This snippet jumps to label `2` if the top of the stack is `0`.

**Length 8**

```
[tab][LF][tab][tab][tab][LF][space][space]
```

Let's write some meaningful programs now! This executes a command to read a number from STDIN and print the corresponding ASCII character.

**Length 9**

```
[space][space][tab][tab][LF][space][space][LF][space]
```

`[space][space][LF][space]` is a command to duplicate the top item on the stack, so this will push the number `-1` onto the stack, then duplicate it.

**Length 10**

```
[space][space][space][tab][space][LF][tab][LF][space][tab]
```

Pushes `2` onto the stack, then prints it.

Comment: Update, please?

Comment: You have already 5 upvotes, could you provide some snippets?

Comment: @nicael sorry I'm lacking the time... I will delete the entry later the day.

Comment: @Min Ok, though I don't think it's right to delete. Maybe someone will fill it with snippets.

Comment: @nicael I could keep the post, but it feels like having upvotes that I shouldn't have :/

Comment: Maybe making it wiki would attract some contributions and solve the "undeserved votes" feeling at the same time?

Comment: Hey, I'd quite like to write a Whitespace answer once I'm home (in about three hours). Are you planning on finishing this? If so, I won't.

Comment: (cough) How's this for some snippets?

Answer (score 14):

## [Detour](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/detour/master/interp.html)

*If you're having difficulty understanding any of these concepts (or, more likely, if I'm explaining them poorly), please feel free to try it yourself on [the online interpreter](http://tiny.cc/detour) which gives a nice visualization of the data moving around. There is also a [TIO site](http://detour.tryitonline.net) but it doesn't have a cell visualization tool*

#### Summary

Detour is a 2D language I made. While most 2D languages revolve around directing the instruction pointer (think [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), [befunge](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge)), this one focuses on redirection of *data/objects*. Each character in the program translates to a *cell*. Each cell will either simply pass on its contents (NOP), modify its contents and pass it on (operations such as addition), or redirect its contents (e.g. pointing its contents downward). More on this later.

#### Factoid

Detour got its name from the "control flow" in the language. I often find myself constructing complex paths to make data travel around the existing data flow, hence "Detour". This is the purest form of [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).

#### Length 1 Snippet

```py
:
```

`:` specifies where input is taken. At the start of the program, all input arguments are pushed to the `:` cell, and then start moving rightward. If no `:` cell is found, one is inserted by default somewhere (usually at the top or middle).

#### Length 2 Snippet

```py
+.
```

This is a program that adds two numbers and outputs the result. The `.` outputs its contents; that's pretty simple. The more complex part would be `+`. `+` is a binary operator which, as you would expect, adds two numbers. The way it adds them, however, is a little weird. In Detour, an operator that takes multiple operands will wait for all its operands to be in the cell before performing the operation.

So let's say a `3` is pushed into a `+` cell. That `3` will stay in that cell until a second number is also pushed into the cell. After our program does its thing, eventually a `4` finds its way into the same `+` cell. Now, it has two operands, and will happily add them together and push the result (`7`) into the next cell.

In this case, the next cell is `.`. Once the two input arguments get onto the `+` cell, their result is pushed to `.`, which outputs the result and exits the program.

#### Length 3 Snippet

```py
$<<
```

Ok, now it's starting to get interesting. `<` is the decrement operator, so it takes `n` and pushes `n-1` to the next cell. `$` is the duplicate operator, it clones its contents, pushing one to the next cell, while the other skips the immediate cell. The first clone usually will then also hit the second cell.

Example:

```py
$<<
4

$<<
 44

$<<
  33

$<<
   23
```

As you can see, `$<<` yields `n-2, n-1`. I use this in my [fibonacci sequence answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence/69796#69796)

#### Length 4 Snippet

```py
[<,]
```

Now it starts to get interesting. `[]` denotes a loop; that is to say, data will pass through it until it is negative or zero. The body of the loop, `<,` does two things: 1) decrement the number; 2) output it. For example, `4[<,]` will output `3210`

#### Length 5 Snippet

```py
[$<<]
```

Now we get to start combining previous snippets (I know, a bit cheaty, but it's late and I'm tired). Remember how in the length 3 snippet we discussed how `n$<<` yields `(n-2, n-1)`? Now imagine if we repeatedly run that process over all generated `n` until they are all ≤ 0? We get the fibonacci sequence!

*Warning: the produced results  will be negative. Take this into account before [using this sequence for something that may pertain to black holes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70652/reverse-engineer-the-n-bonacci-sequences#comment172902_70652)*

### Length 6 Snippet

```py
g>d$G+
```

This calculates, given `n`, `n + (n + 1) / 2`. While this is not very useful, it demonstrates an important concept: registers. `g` stores a value in the register, while `G` retrieves it. What happens is the number gets stored in `g`. Then it walks through, getting incremented (`>`), cut in half (`d`), then duplicated (`$`). The new value (`(n+1)/2`) gets added to the value stored in `g` (`n`). This yields `n + (n+1)/2`. Here we start getting into the complicated stuff that's hard to explain with words, feel free to [try it in the interpreter](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/detour/master/interp.html?hex=Omc+ZCRHKy4K).

*Registers are used in [my fibonacci sequence answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence/69796#69796) (the 30-byte solution) to store the value of `sqrt(5)`.*

### Length 7 Snippet

```py
<Q.
;d<
```

This is again kind of nonsensical, but demonstrates two key components of Detour.

1. Control flow (`Q`)
2. Recursion (`;`)

First off, Control Flow.

As mentioned in the intro, control flow in Detour is pretty nonstandard. In Detour, control flow cells manipulate an object's direction or location rather than its value. We have seen some control flow in the form of `$` and `[]`. 

As in the example, `Q` *conditionally* redirects objects: that is, it will move an object depending on the object's value. In `Q`'s case, it will push the object down (put keep it pointed in the same direction) if it is positive, and will push it forward otherwise.

Recursion (`;`) is another type of control flow. `;` will move an object to the start of the program (where the input came through, or more concisely, the location of the `:` cell).

Combining these two things, we can see what the snippet does

- take input `n`
- decrement it
- If `n >= 0`, push it down

  - halve it, then decrement it and move it back to the start (lines wrap around in Detour making `;>d` equivalent to  `>d;`)
- Else, push it forward

  - output it.

This can be translated to the following Python program:

```py
def f(n):
  n -= 1      # <
  if n <= 0:  # Q
    print(n)    # .
  else:       # Q
    n /= 2      # d
    n -= 1      # <
    f(n)        # ;

f(input())
```

### Length 9 Snippet

```py
<Q>S.
;$<
```

This is a recursive fibonacci definition. `S` sums up all items pushed to it. The bottom uses the fact that objects can wrap around the edges, so `;$<` is identical to `$<;` with a leading space.

Answer (score 14):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog)

#### Factoid

Brachylog is a declarative logic programming language based on Prolog. Its name is constituted of the prefix *brachy-* (meaning *short*, from ancient greek *βραχύς*) and the suffix *-log*, to mark its link to Prolog.

#### Length 1

```
r
```

A seemingly simple program, that is useful to understand some fundamental basics about Brachylog (and declarative programming in general): Reverse something.

In Brachylog, the program `r` is a main predicate consisting of one rule (namely, `r`). All rules in Brachylog implicitely start with the Input (noted `?`) and end with the Output (noted `.`).

Therefore, our program is really `?r.`, which can be read as *Output is the reverse of the Input*. The built-in `r - Reverse` works on the three main data types of Brachylog: [lists](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=cg&input=WzE6InRlc3QiOjI6IlBQQ0ciXQ&args=Wg), [strings](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=cg&input=InRlc3Qi&args=Wg) and [integers](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=cg&input=MTIzNDU&args=Wg).

But more interestingly, it is a *relationship* that we state with `r`, not a one-way function like most programming languages. As such, `r` also works as expected [when the Output is ground and the Input is not!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=cg&input=Wg&args=WzE6InRlc3QiOjI6IlBQQ0ciXQ) It even works if both the input and the output have no value, though that doesn't show well on the online interpreter and with a program limited to one character.

We will continues to see in the next examples that predicates in Brachylog are relationships between variables and are as such much more expressive than traditional imperative function. We can also note that the Input and Output of predicates are merely called that because that's usually how those variables are used, but those are simply names and they don't mean that for example the Input necessarily has to be a ground variable.

#### Length 2

```
r?
```

Now that we know that `r` is *reverse*, and that `?` is the Input, you can probably guess what this program does: test whether the input is a palindrome or not.

Indeed, `r?` is really `?r?.`, which can be read as: *Input is the reverse of the Input, and Output is the same as the Input*. Since we do not need the Output at all here, the second part of the sentence can be disregarded and we then see that it is indeed a palindromeness checking program.

The program [`.r`](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=LnI&input=&args=MTIzNDU0MzIx) would have worked the same if we passed our input through the Output variable.

#### Length 3

```
:^a
```

As you can see from the TIO link, the code above squares each element of the input. `^` being the squaring built-in predicate, and `a` being *Apply*, a *meta-predicate*.

In Brachylog, all predicates have only an input and an output argument. Therefore, when we need to "pass" more than one thing to the predicate, we put them in a list.

This is what we are doing with `:`, which is also the list separator. By writing `:^`, we are constructing the list `[Input, brachylog_power]`. So, just like numbers, strings and lists, we can also put *predicates* in lists.

*Apply* takes the last element of its input argument as being a predicate, and queries that predicate each time with an element of the rest of its input argument as input (hence why it is called a meta-predicate). The output of *apply* accumulates the outputs of the queries. This predicate is usually called `map` in other languages (`maplist` in Prolog).

#### Length 4

```
:@[f
```

Continuing on meta-predicates, here is `f`: *Findall*. As its name suggests, this will find all valid outputs of a predicate for a specific input.

Here, the input to *Findall* is the list `[Input, brachylog_string_prefix]`. The predicate *string_prefix* `@[` is true if its output is a prefix of the input. By running *Findall* on it, we will obtain all prefixes of `?`.

Note that the *string* in *string_prefix* only comes from the fact that it is a 2 symbols predicate which starts with `@` (which represent operations that are more often done on strings). This predicate of course doesn't only work on strings, but also on integers and lists.

#### Length 5

```
:Lc.r
```

This is probably my favorite Brachylog program (most likely because [it is twice as short as the Jelly answer on this challenge!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77095/palindromizing-the-strings)). This is a program which palindromizes its input.

In Brachylog, strings and integers can contain variable characters/digits, just like how lists can contain variables as elements. Therefore, `:Lc.` means *“Output is the result of concatenating the Input and a variable `L`”*. Then, we impose with `.r` that the output reversed is still the output (thus, that the output is a palindrome). This will force Brachylog to **unify** the variable values of `L` so that the output is indeed a palindrome.

#### Length 6

```
:1f
~c
```

Here is another example of the use of `f - Findall` and `c - Concatenate`.

The first line is the main predicate and states *“Find all valid outputs of predicate 1 given the Input as input”*. The second line is predicate 1 and states `The output, when concatenated, results in the Input`.

Here, `~` is a simple control symbol which "flips" the arguments of the following predicate: `AcZ` means “`Z` is the result of concatenating the elements of `A`” whereas `A~cZ` means “concatenating the elements of `Z` results in `A`”.

Therefore the program above will find all possible lists of strings (excluding the ones containing the empty string), which when concatenated will result in the input.

Note that `~c` is not a second built-in which does the reverse of `c` ; it **is** the same as `c`, but called with swapped arguments. To convince you of this, [rewriting predicate 1 as `,.c?,` will result in the same program](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OjFmCiwuYz8s&input=InRlc3Qi&args=Wg).

Side note: this program could have been written `:{~c}f`, which does the exact same thing. Choosing one or the other is mostly a matter of preference.

#### Length 7

```
:1y
#p=
```

This demonstrates another meta-predicate: `y - Yield`, and a major feature of Brachylog: constraints-based arithmetic.

`y - Yield` is a meta predicate very similar to `f - Findall`, the difference between the two being that `y` will unify its output with the first `N` outputs of the queried predicate (`N` being the penultimate element of the input arguments), instead of all of the outputs. This is thus very useful for predicates that have an infinite number of choice points, such as arithmetic series.

In Brachylog, all integer arithmetic is based on **constraints**. This makes operations on integers very declarative in nature ; if we declare the relationship that `X + Y = Z` (which in Brachylog would be written as `X:Y+Z`), then this constraint will hold even if those variables have no ground value. Adding more and more constraints will keep on reducing the search space for the possible values of those variables. Then, the labeling process (using `=` in Brachylog) will assign values to variables such that they respect all constraints that were applied to them.

`#p - constraint_prime` is a predicate which constrains its input `?` (which is unified with its output `.`) such that it must be a prime number. Using `= - Equals`, we can then label that variable so that it takes a ground value. The labeling process will order choice points according to the magnitude of the values, which is why overall this program yields the first `N` prime numbers, starting from `2`.

#### Length 8

```
~l<:#pa=
```

As you can see, this does exactly the same thing as the previous 7 bytes program. This one though is much more easier to describe and understand.

We use `~l` to get a list whose length is the Input. We then impose with `<` that the list must contain integers and must be strictly increasing. Using `Apply`, `:#pa` then constrains each integer of the list to be a prime number. We then use `=` to label the values of that list, which results in a strictly increasing list of prime numbers.

#### Length 9

```
#0|@e+:0&
```

This program computes the [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) of its input.

Just like in Prolog, we can write multiple rules for a single predicate, using `|`: the first rule `#0` constrains the Input = the Ouput to be a single digit. If this is not possible, the second rule `@e+:0&` will split the input as a list of digits, then sum them and call Predicate 0 (the main predicate) recursively.

Answer (score 14):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak)

**Factoid:**

In Brain-Flak a one is shorter than zero and multiplying by seven takes more characters than multiplying by eight.

*Since Brain-Flak programs must have an even number of characters I have added some programs with extra spaces for the odd length snippets.  These are not well golfed intentionally but rather put there in an attempt to give you a little more for your kind upvotes.*

#### Length 2 snippet

```
<>
```

It switches to the offstack.  As a single program this will always output nothing regardless of the inputs.

#### Length 3 snippet

```
{ }
```

This is the `{}` nilad it pops top item on the stack and returns its value.  As a full program it just removes the last item input.

#### Length 4 snippet

```
(())
```

This program pushes one to the top of the stack.  This is the shortest way to express 1 in Brain-Flak.

#### Length 5 snippet

```
([ ])
```

This program pushes the stack height to the top of the stack.  At the start of a program it acts like `argc`.

#### Length 6 snippet

```
({}{})
```

This program adds two numbers.

It pops the top two elements and pushes the sum.

#### Length 7 snippet

This one requires a `-d` flag to run so +3 bytes

(This one also doesn't work on try it online)

```
@ij
```

This is the injection flag! (With a space after it because it needs to be length 7)

This halts the program takes a Brain-Flak program from STDIN and runs it as part of the code.  Its my favorite flag and (arguably) Brain-Flak's shortest self interpreter.  `@ij` flags can be nested

#### Length 8 snippet

```
({}<>)<>
```

This snippet moves the top of the current stack to the other stack.  It is a useful component of many programs.  It starts by opening a push with `(` pops the first value with `{}`, moves to the other stack using `<>` and puts the popped value down using `)`.  When that is done it moves back to the original stack with a `<>`.

#### Length 9 snippet

```
({}[()])
```

*(One space after the program makes it 9 characters)*

This snippet decrements the top of the stack by one.  It works by popping the top of the stack with `{}` and adding it to the negative of `()` (-1) and then pushing the result back on the stack.

#### Length 10 snippet

```
{({}<>)<>}
```

This snippet will move values from one stack to another until it encounters a zero.  In many programs where it is known that the stack does not contain a zero this is used as a cheap stack reverse.

#### Length 12 snippet

```
({}<({}())>)
```

We've finally gotten long enough snippets that we can show off the usefulness of the `<...>` monad. This program increments the number underneath the top of the stack, while leaving the TOS intact. This approach can be extended. For example, this will increment the number second from the top of the stack:

```
({}<({}<({}())>)>)
```

In general, you can do:

```
'({}<' * n + <code> + '>)' * n
```

to run `<code>` on the number that's *n* from the top without affecting the rest of the stack.

Comment: Unfortunately you won't be able to post as much since brain-flak has to have an even source code length.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I can use debug flags for the odd ones

Comment: Or you could double everything. I'm not sure how valid that is though

Comment: @DJMcMayhem that would not be valid see: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/546/31203

Answer (score 13):

## Prelude

Prelude is an esoteric language with 9 instructions, plus the numeric literals 0 through 9. It was created as an ASCII representation of a music-based language called Fugue, which for some strange reason has not been implemented.

## Prelude

**Length 5**

```
 v
^#
```

This is a 2-dimensional code snippet, so I'm not sure if the newline should count. Anyway, what it does is to duplicate the top of the first line's stack. The `^` instruction makes a copy of the top of the above line's stack. `v` copies the top of the below line's stack. `#` destroys the number on the top of the stack.

**Length 4**

```
3(5)
```

Everyone loves a stack overflow. The above code pushes infinite amounts of fives onto the stack.

**Length 3**

```
9()
```

This program creates an infinite loop, because infinite loops are very important. `9` pushes the value 9 onto the stack. `()` is a loop that repeats as long as the top value on the stack of the line where `(` is is nonzero.

**Length 2**

```
?!
```

This handy utility finds the ASCII value of a character. The `?` command inputs one character and places it atop the stack. At least with the default behavior of the official Python interpreter, input is character-based and output is numeric.

**Length 1**

```
!
```

Prelude is a stack-based language in which each line of the program has a separate stack. The stacks are conveniently supplied with an infinite amount of zeroes. `!` is an instruction which outputs the top of the stack. Thus, the program `!` outputs 0.

Comment: Shouldn't it be an error since the stack is empty?

Comment: @AdamSpeight The stack is never empty. The stack is initialised to a infinite number of 0. So if you do anything on the empty stack it pops a 0. But then there's still an infinite number of them. Pretty nifty. :)

Answer (score 13):

## [Jagl](http://github.com/globby/jagl)

**7 Characters**

```
()(1)GF
```

In Jagl, `F` is a recursive flatten. You can have many nested arrays and it will flatten them into one. Another little trick is, if you have an array of numbers (and arrays of numbers and so on), and just want to flatten one deep, you can just use `b` (the sum function) to do that.

**6 Characters**

```
(1(1))
```

The array definition syntax in Jagl uses spaces to separate items, but in some cases, the spaces can be omitted, reducing the character count of the program. Alternatively, this could be written `1(1)G` in this case, to reduce the characters even more.

**5 Characters**

```
5r[/B
```

Computes 5 factorial. Makes a range of 0 to 4 inclusive, increments all of the numbers by one, and pushes the product to stack.

**4 Characters**

```
1 2G
```

It only takes one character to encase the whole stack in an array. Alternatively, using a lowercase `g` would take up to 2 values from the stack and encase them in an array!

**3 Characters**

```
m%p
```

It only takes three characters to filter an array on the stack for all primes, and print the results

**2 Characters**

```
T~
```

To make a self interpreter in Jagl, all it takes is two characters! (though, it would take 6 to make it loop endlessly)

**1 Character**

```
m
```

The function `m` in Jagl is the isPrime function, so it only takes a few characters to, say, print the primes from 1 to 1000.

**Factoid:** Jagl was created as a high school project, and the name stands for Just A Golfing Language

Answer (score 13):

## Clojure

Clojure is a variant of Lisp which runs on the Java virtual machine and the .Net virtual machine. A cross-compiler is also available which will turn Clojure code into JavaScript, and thus Clojure code can be run on just about any computer. Clojure can be written in a functional style which is what got me interested in it.

**Length 1 Snippet**

`;` - comments begin with a semi-colon and run until the end-of-line. This is also a valid (if not particularly interesting :-) one-character program.

**Length 2 Snippet**

One of the strengths of any Lisp-style language is its built-in support for collections. In Clojure there are three main collection types:

- Lists, which are groups of values surrounded by parentheses - `()`
- Vectors, which are groups of values surrounded by square braces - `[]`
- Maps, which are pairs of values surrounded by curly braces - `{}`

Lists are both a data structure and the basis for all programming because all programs in Clojure consist of Lists of function names and arguments (Lisp was originally an acronym which stood for List Processor). An empty List (`()`), Vector (`[]`), or Map (`{}`) is also a valid (if uninteresting) program.

**Length 3 Snippet**

Invoking a function in Clojure is done by putting the function name first in a list (also known as a sequence), followed by its arguments. For example, if we have a function named `a` then we would invoke it as `(a)`, assuming it takes no arguments.

**Length 4 Snippet**

@user100464's comment got me thinking about quoted forms. A quoted form is introduced with a back-quote character, so

```
`(a)
```

is a quoted form which will invoke the function `a` when the quoted form is executed. (This can also be written as `(quote (a))`). According to [this blog posting by Colin Jones](https://blog.8thlight.com/colin-jones/2012/05/22/quoting-without-confusion.html), quoting is "one of the most Lispy of the Lisp features". Colin's blog post goes into a good amount of detail about using quoting in Clojure macro definitions (which IMO is a topic worthy of entire books) - however, let's simply say that you can evaluate a quoted form using the (you guessed it) `eval` function. So let's say we create a simple function `a` with

```
(defn a [] (println "a invoked"))
```

which we can invoke from the REPL with the "normal" unquoted form

```
(a)
```

which prints

```
a invoked
```

Cool. Now let's create a quoted form which will execute our function `a`:

```
(def quota `(a))
```

We can then invoke it with

```
(eval quota)
```

which prints

```
a invoked
```

So at its most basic level quoting allows us to create a form to invoke a function, then keep that form hanging around uninvoked until we want to invoke it. For those familiar with C a quoted form is a bit like a function pointer, allowing you to save up the ability to invoke a function anonymously until you're ready to do so. (Lispers - please don't start in on me. Yes, I know what I just said is hideously inaccurate and nearly-but-not-quite completely wrong. However, it's "lies to children" (ref. Terry Pratchett et al in his "Science of Discworld" series). If you think explaining nuclear physics to wizards is easy, *you* try it! :-) ((Rant on) And C'ers - please don't take offense. I wrote C et se derivees on a daily basis for over 10 years, Back In The Day. I don't anymore. Why? Simple - Moore's Law won. Due to CPU speed increases execution time has become a DRM issue - i.e. whether a compiled-and-optimized C program takes 0.0001 seconds to execute vs. an ugly, slow interpreted language version of the same program taking 0.1 seconds to execute Doesn't Really Matter - the user pushes Enter and the answer comes out before their finger lifts off the key. My day job is writing boring back-office code for a major retailer using Oracle's PL/SQL language (think "Ada with embedded SQL"). The byte-code interpreter is pretty good - but execution time is absolutely dominated by SQL execution time Every Single Time, so it's not that the PL/SQL byte-code interpreter is so great, it's that the CPU is sufficiently fast and the database is so much the elephant in the room that faster execution of non-database code Doesn't Really Matter. (Rant off) :-).

**Length 5 Snippet**

An example of invoking a function `f` with a single argument `1` would look like

```
(f 1)
```

**Length 6 Snippet**

**Length 7 Snippet**

```
(recur)
```

Ooooh! Tail recursion! Oooooh!

OK, now that we've gotten over that - WHAT THE HECK IS TAIL RECURSION?!?!? And I don't actually HAVE a tail - can I still use it?!?

Yes - yes, you can.

Tail recursion is a nice way of saying "Branching back to the start of the function (or some other point) instead of making a time-and-memory-consuming recursive function call". Recursive function calls do nasty things like consuming stack space, which is in limited supply and when it's gone, so's your program.

And oh-by-the-way, in Clojure you *have* to use tail recursion if you want to do any kind of looping. It's just kind of what you do.

Tail recursion in Clojure is done by using the `recur` form, which takes a variable number of values (see the Length 11 Snippet below for more information), binds those values to the bindings at the recursion point (say *what*?!?), and then jumps back to the recursion point. And oh-by-the-way - `(recur)` must be in tail position. (HUH?!?!?).

OK, let's explain.

First, what's a recursion point? A recursion point is a point in the program you can recurse back to. (Oh, thanks...). No, seriously - there are only two recursion points in Clojure - either the beginning of a function (in other words a `(defn...` or `(fn...` form) or the top of a loop (i.e. the `(loop...` form).

So, why all this agony to do looping? Why not something like `(for (= i 0) (<= i 10) (+ i 1))`? Recall if you will that, in general, "variables" in Clojure DON'T CHANGE - in other words, variables are really constants. (Clojure cognoscenti: "lies to children", OK?). Thus, you don't (usually) assign a new value to a "variable", and thus you can't do the usual "loop" thing where you change the value of the loop control variable.

So what you do in Clojure is, you re-bind the function-or-loop parameters to new values, then re-run the function-or-loop against those new values. Hopefully, since you're doing recursion (and nobody likes an infinite recurser :-) you've got something in the body of your recursive code which forces the recursion to terminate. If not - well, then you can use your CPU to grill hot dogs... :-)

And, oh yeah - "tail position". [There's a really good explanation of it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813497/clojure-what-exactly-is-tail-position-for-recur), but suffice to say that an expression is in tail position if it would be returned from the form - i.e. it's not followed by any other form executions.

Now, in some Lisps tail recursion is performed by executing a form which calls the function the code is currently in. The compiler recognizes this and turns the call into a tail-recursive branch back to the beginning of the function if it can - so you'd see something like

```
(defn some-func [n]
  (if (< n 10)
    (do                       ; then case
      (printf "loop continues %d\n" n)
      (some-func (inc n)))
    (printf "loop done\n")))  ; else case
```

where `(some-func (inc n))` would be a tail-recursive invocation of `some-func`.

The problem is that if the recursive form invocation isn't truly in tail position it will still be compiled properly by the compiler (it's valid code, after all) - but it will become a stack-consuming function call, which can cause your program to blow up unexpectedly, and it can be very difficult to figure out what's gone wrong.

Clojure's solution is to use the special `recur` form to indicate that a tail-recursive loop is desired. The compiler checks to ensure that the `recur` form is in tail position - i.e. that there are no form invocations which follow it in the loop - and then generates to code to re-bind arguments and branch back to the recursion point. In this manner you're guaranteed to get a truly tail-recursive branch or else you get a compiler error. Thus, in Clojure `some-func` would be:

```
(defn some-func [n]
  (if (< n 10)
    (do                       ; then case
      (printf "loop continues %d\n" n)
      (recur (inc n)))
    (printf "loop done\n")))  ; else case
```

For other examples of the use of `(recur)` look a bit further down the page to the Length 11 Snippet.

**Length 8 Snippet**

**Length 9 Snippet**

**Length 10 Snippet**

**Length 11 Snippet**

```
(sum 1 2 3)
```

One of the things I like about Clojure is its handling of variable numbers of parameters to a function. Let's say that you want to write a function named `sum` to sum up a bunch of numbers (which is a completely *stupid* thing to do in Clojure, as it already has a very nice function called `+` which does exactly that - so `(+ 1 2)` returns 3, `(+ 1 2 3 4)` returns 10, and so on - but we'll do it anyways, not because we're stupid, but because we're writing a snippet to explain a concept :-). Well, golly, you say, if I want to enter `(sum 1 2)`, that's a function which takes two arguments; but if I want to add up three arguments that would be `(sum 1 2 3)`, which would be a different function; and then `(sum 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 987654321)` would be Yet Another Function, etc, ad nauseum. It sure would be nice if there was a way to let a function just take in all the arguments someone wanted to pass, without having to explicitly name them every time. And, of course, there is... :-)

In Clojure you specify a function which takes a variable number of parameters thusly:

```
(defn a-func [arg1 arg2 & more-args] ... )
```

This function requires two arguments `arg1` and `arg2`, and accepts an undefined number of additional arguments which are put into a vector and bound to the argument `more-args`. So let's see how we'd take advantage of this to write a `sum` function:

```
(defn sum [n & more-n]
  (loop [ tot     0
          num     n
          rest-n  more-n ]
  (if (> (count rest-n) 0)
    (recur (+ tot num) (first rest-n) (rest rest-n))
    (+ tot num))))
```

Here we define a function `sum` which takes *at least* one argument, named `n`, and optionally takes a bunch of other arguments which will be lumped together into `more-n`. Inside the function we create a loop (which is, if you recall, a recursion point) which defines several bindings: `tot` is the summed total of all the arguments, which will be returned later; 'num', which is the number we're working with right now; and `rest-n` which is the rest of our numbers.

Note that a slightly more Lisp-y way to define our `sum` function is to use a "worker" function to do all the actual summation work instead of a loop:

```
(defn sum-all [tot n more-n]
  (if (> (count more-n) 0)
    (recur (+ tot n) (first more-n) (rest more-n))
    (+ tot n)))

(defn sum [n & more-n]
  (sum-all 0 n more-n))
```

This version turns the `loop` of the first version into a separate function, which then recursively re-invokes itself.

So now you know a bit about handling variable numbers of arguments in Clojure.

---

(Trying to make snippets for a rather verbose language like Clojure is relatively difficult. To quote AC/DC, "I'll tell you, folks, it's harder than it looks...") (And no, I'm not going to play the bagpipes :-)

Comment: Length 4 could be `'(1)` for an unevaluated list of length 1

Comment: @user100464 - thanks for the interesting idea. :-)

Answer (score 13):

## [Fuzzy Octo Guacamole](https://github.com/RikerW/Fuzzy-Octo-Guacamole)

#### Factoid:

Do to the longness of the name, Fuzzy Octo Guacamole is also known as FOG, and rarely Fuzztoguac.

## Length 1:

```
:
```

Prints `[]`, which is the empty stack.  As you may guess, `:` prints the stack.

## Length 2:

```
_;
```

Prints `0` because popping (`_`) from an empty stack gives `0`.  `;` prints.

Alternative:

```
^=
```

This is the `sign` function. It returns `1` if `x > 0`, `0` if `x = 0`, and `-1` if `x < 0`.  It prints due to implicit output.

## Length 3:

```
^_;
```

A simple cat program.  The `^` gets input.

Alternative:

```
^d*
```

Prints n<sup>2</sup> if n is a number, else n.

Alternative:

```
(^)
```

A infinite cat program, shortened.  Loops have implicit output <s>due to a bug tagged `wontfix`</s>.

## Length 4:

```
(_;)
```

Prints `0` forever.  The `(` and `)` denote the start and end of a infinite loop, and the `_;` pops from the empty stack (giving `0`) and prints.

Alternate:

```
_UNK
```

Also happens to be a quine.  `_` sets the temp var to `0`, `U` pushes `0`, and `N` pushes `None`.  The `K` prints `_UNK`.

Alternate #2:

```
(+X)
```

Counts up forever, printing each number. Swapping the `+` and `X` makes it start at `0`.

Alternate #3:

Prints a goat out of ASCII art. Thanks to @Downgoat for this suggestion.

```
                      ___.
                     //  \\
                    ((   ''
                     \\__,
                    /6 (%)\,
                   (__/:";,;\--____----_
                    ;; :';,:';`;,';,;';`,`_
                      ;:,;;';';,;':,';';,-Y\
                       ;,;,;';';,;':;';'; Z/
                       / ;,';';,;';,;';;'
                      / / |';/~~~~~\';;'
                     ( K  | |      || |
                      \_\ | |      || |
                       \Z | |      || |
                          L_|      LL_|
                          LW/      LLW/
```

## Length 5:

```
^{i}:
```

Prints a list with the input if it is truthy, or another truthy value of the same type as the input.  e.g. `1` -> `[1]`, `0` -> `[1]`, `asd` -> `[u'asd']`.

Note: The `u` is due to unicode formatting.

Alternate:

```
^^s=i
```

Outputs `True` if the 2 inputs are equal, else `False`.

Alternate #2:

```
^s^$:
```

Prints inclusive range of the 2 inputs, so `2, 4` gives `[2, 3, 4]`

Outputs `[]` if input 2 > input 1.

## Length 6:

```
^![_;]
```

Prints your input as many times as itself. i.e. `3` -> `3\n3\n3\n`, `1` -> `1\n`, `as` -> `ad\nas\n`.  The last one is because the counter sets itself to the length of the ToS if it is a string.

## Length 7

```
^X({@})
```

This is a truth machine.  The `^` gets input, the `X` prints the ToS without popping (equivalent to `o;`), and the `({@})` ends the program if the ToS is `0`.

Alternate:

```
#--repl
```

This starts the REPL, which is like a infinite prompt for code.  But the stack is persistent, and implicit output always applies.

---

At this point in time, many changes were made to Fuzzy Octo Guacamole, including a REPL, implicit output and the `X` command.

The older snippets are staying the same, but I am adding a new alternative snippet for each length.

---

## Length 8:

```
$--!++[*]
```

This works either as a function (add a `^` before), or in the REPL. (type the number, hit enter, paste this, hit enter).

## Length 9:

```
2pP*.2P**
```

This calculates the area and circumference of a circle, assuming each stack has the input already. In the REPL, this can be done with `^C`.  The results are left on the stacks.

## Length 10:

```
22^p2^pSpX
```

Output the product of the difference and the sum of two inputs, squared.  [(From a CMC (chat-mini-challenge) by Conor O'Brien)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=33020419#33020419)

`2` pushes 2 to the stack, then `2^` pushes 2 and gets input and `p` raises it to the 2nd power (because of that 2 we pushed).

The same is done again with the `2^p`.

Then we subtract the squared numbers we got, and square them (using that first `2` we pushed at the beginning). Finally, `X` peeks and pops.

This uses the difference of squares formula, `(x - y)(x + y) = x^2 - y^2`.

## Length 11:

```
"Hello, "^j
```

Prints `Hello, <input>`. Pretty simple.

Comment: Snippet 4 alt #3 is a very good feature, I wish I could upvote again just for that +2

Comment: Snippet 4 is my new gmail sign off.

Answer (score 12):

### Burlesque

Burlesque is a stack-based, lazy, concatenative esoteric programming language.
It was designed as a utility for students of computer science but it has become a language used for golfing. Since Burlesque has two character built-ins programs obviously grow twice as fast as programs in golfing languages with one character built-ins do. Burlesque is more like a command line utility tool for easy homework or related things like when you need to know what that number in base 4 is or what are the subsequences of this set or what are the permutations of this string and the like.

Burlesque has 400+ built-ins and growing. This also means that Burlesque's power stems from two main factors: The laziness and the amount of built-ins. The drawback is that the language is not very verbose and you can't infer what a code is doing by simply looking at the syntax and control structures since those don't really exist in Burlesque. The only way to understand Burlesque programs is by either looking everything up all the time or by memorizing a lot of built-ins.

Website: http://mroman.ch/burlesque/

**Length 1**

Cat program:

```
# Q
$ echo -n "123" | ./blsq --stdin "Q"
```

**Length 2**

Reverse a list:

```
# <-
$ ./blsq --no-stdin "{1 2 3}<-"
{3 2 1}
```

**Length 3**

Reverse STDIN:

```
# <-Q
$ echo -n "123" | ./blsq --stdin "<-Q"
321
```

**Length 4**

Add two numbers read from STDIN:

```
# ps++
$ echo "12 13" | ./blsq --stdin "ps++"
25
```

**Length 5**

Show all reversed substrings:

```
# su)<-
$ echo -n "1234" | ./blsq --stdin "su)<-"
{"1" "2" "3" "4" "21" "32" "43" "321" "432" "4321"}
```

**Length 6**

Read integer from STDIN and calculate sum[1..N]:

```
# riro++
$ echo -n "5" | ./blsq --stdin "riro++"
15
```

**Length 7**

Read integer from STDIN and calculate 10^n:

```
# ri10j^?
$ echo -n "5" | ./blsq --stdin "ri10j?^"
100000
```

**Length 8**

Repeat a line from STDIN `length(line)` times (trailing newline required):

```
# ~]sa.*uN
$ echo "abcd" | blsq --stdin "~]sa.*uN"
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
$ echo "abc" | blsq --stdin "~]sa.*uN"
abc
abc
abc
```

**Length 9**

Chance that we have exactly 0 successes within 8 tries where p=0.1 (binomial distribution):

```
blsq ) 8 0.1 0Bp
0.4304672100000001
```

**Length 10**

Convert from RGB to hex ([challenge on codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/13132/color-rgb-int-to-hex)):

```
blsq ) "72 61 139"psb6\['#+]
"#483d8b"
```

Answer (score 12):

## [Snap](https://snap.berkeley.edu/)*!*

Snap! is a language based off of [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/).
Scratch answer: [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53206/41061)

Note: These are things specific to Snap.

#### Factoid

Snap!'s old name was BYOB, for Build Your Own Blocks. The creators were forced to change it because some teachers at Berkeley, where it was based, had no sense of humor.

#### Length 1 Snippet

[image: unicode65asletter]

Unicode support is available!

#### Length 2 Snippet

This one only works if you load the toolblocks (the smaller button on the page). IMO, you should always load the toolblocks.

[image: b2r]

You can convert blocks to reporters (things that contain numbers). This way, whenever a reporter would be needed, you can use a block!

#### Length 3 Snippet

[image]
<sub>(source: [cubeupload.com](https://i.cubeupload.com/F92eSq.jpg))</sub>

Ternary operators and writing to the screen! This will print hi because an empty boolean slot is FALSE.

Answer (score 12):

## LiveScript

Factoid: LiveScript was on of the early names of JavaScript (mocha is another one), before the need to "make it feel entreprise-y" came up.
The language offers features that spans in different paradigms (mostly functional and object-oriented).

#### 1 vote

```
@
```

This is simply a shortcut for "this", or property access into "this".

#### 2 votes

```
->
```

We can define a function! Albeit empty for now.

#### 3 votes

```
(+)
```

The language allows you to use binary operators as functions. They're also curried!

#### 4 votes

```
v|>f
```

The pipe is, like in F#, a "reversed" function application: the above is equivalent to `f(v)`.

As a bonus, the opposite operator also exists: (like `$` in Haskell)

```
f<|v
```

which is equivalent to `f(v)` (this is useful for precedence).

(of the two, `<|` has lowest precedence).

#### 5 votes

```
class
```

Yes, this actually works as a standalone anonymous classes. They're values, and very powerful – they have executable bodies (a bit like Ruby). This allows to declare method on-the-fly, but that's going to be a bit later :).

#### 6 votes

```
"#{3}"
```

String interpolation! It's particularly powerful in LiveScript, where there's even a shortcut for interpolation variables – the braces aren't needed: `"#x"`

#### 7 votes

```
->|_=>1
```

This is a bit useless as-is... but in LiveScript, `switch`es are implicit right after a function declaration (`->`), and a case can also be spelled `|` (ML-style). The `=>` is an alias for `then` (but doesn't require spaces around it), and `_` is a catch-all.

This is basically the sugar-y syntax for (a topic-less `switch` will switch on truthiness):

```
->
 switch
 # case ...
 otherwise
   1
```

#### 8 votes

```
@a{}b[]c
```

`@a` is simply `@.a`, which is... `this.a`! The language inserts dot for you in my places.

In LiveScript, `[]` and `{}` used as infix operators (they're actually infix dot operators, the real spelling is `.{}` and `.[]`, but those dots can be inferred) are (semi)autovivification (like in Perl)/shaping member access.

(contrarily to perl, you need to use `{}` and `[]`, hence the **semi**autovivification)

It means `a{}b` (or `a.{}b`) tries to access `a.b`, but if that key doesn't exist (or is `== null`), it creates it as an empty object (`{}`). For `a[]b`, it does the same, but initializes an empty array (`[]`) instead.

The postfix `!` is actually simply `()`, an argumentless call. Here again, the language will insert dot as needed:

```
a!b
a()b
# both mean
a().b
# and equally...
a()['b']
```

Comment: What's `f<|v|>g` do in terms of precedence?

Comment: @cat `<|` has the lowest precedence (it used to have an even lower precedence than `=`, which was a bit of an issue)

Comment: So it's equivalent to `f <| (v |> g)`. Interesting.

Answer (score 12):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E)

#### Length 7 snippet:

Code [[**Try it online!**](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCdxbjihKIs4oCaw68h&input=)]:

```
”Ÿ™,‚ï!
```

This is using a *dictionary* compression method. This will result into **Hello, World!**. Every ASCII character is interpreted as a normal character and every character with a code point above 127 is used for the decompression itself:

```
”       # Start a compressed string with all words titlecased
 Ÿ      # In Info.txt, you can see that this has index 24
  ™     # Index 19
        # These two indexes combined is 2419, in the dictionary you can see that the
          2419th word is hello
   ,    # Since this has no index, this will be interpreted as a normal character
    ‚ï  # Index 0118, which is the word "world". An extra space before this word is
        # implicitly added.
      ! # Regular exclamation mark
        # All the compressed words are automatically title cased.
          resulting in: "Hello, World!"
```

#### Length 6 snippet:

Code [[**Try it online!**](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RD1nR8OBPQ&input=SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ)]

```
D=gGÁ=
```

This creates a square with a rotating string. For example, the input `Hello` would result into:

```
Hello
oHell
loHel
lloHe
elloH
```

The input is first `D`uplicated, then printed with a newline *without* popping (using `=`). We take the len`g`th of the string, and create a for loop with `G` and each time we rotate the string 1 to the right using `Á` and print it again without popping. This is done `length - 1` times, so in total this is done in `length` times.

#### Length 5 snippet:

Code [[**Try it online!**](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xb5uxb5v4oCh&input=QWJjRGVm)]:

```
žnžo‡
```

This does the *Atbash* cipher. The `ž` command contains all kind of shortcuts to constants. Right now, the list of constants is:

```
ž 23  > ža           push current hours
        žb           push current minutes
        žc           push current seconds
        žd           push current microseconds
        že           push current day
        žf           push current month
        žg           push current year
        žh           push [0-9]
        ži           push [a-zA-Z]
        žj           push [a-zA-Z0-9_]
        žk           push [z-aZ-A]
        žl           push [z-aZ-A9-0_]
        žm           push [9-0]
        žn           push [A-Za-z]
        žo           push [Z-Az-a]
        žp           push [Z-A]
```

So, we can conclude that `žn` is equal to `[A-Za-z]` and `žo` is equal to `[Z-Az-a]`. After this, we just perform a transliteration using `‡`.

#### Length 4 snippet:

Code [[**Try it online!**](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xZJ2eSw&input=YWJjZGU)]:

```
Œvy,
```

This is maybe not a very tricky one, but certainly interesting. The `Œ` command computes all *substring* that can be made with the string. Then, we map over the array containing all the substrings using `v`. `y` is the variable which holds the string and `,` prints that with a newline.

#### Length 3 snippet:

Code [[**Try it online!**](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=wrPCucKy&input=QUJDCkRFRgpHSEk&args=LWQ)]:

```
³¹²
```

This is using a pretty neat feature of 05AB1E. What this does is pushing the third input, then the first and then the second. You can see this best with the debug mode on.

#### Length 2 snippet:

Code [[**Try it online!**](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=TE8&input=NA&args=LWQ)]:

```
LO
```

This calculates **(n × (n - 1)) / 2**, which is also the formula for [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). What this does it make a `L`ist in the range `[1 .. input]` and then calculates the sum using `O`.

#### Length 1 snippet:

Code [**[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=IQ&input=MTA)**]:

```
!
```

Well, this isn't particularly interesting except the fact that input is *implicit*. When the length of the stack is smaller than the arity of a function, input is used instead. This just calculates the factorial of the input.

#### Factoid

05AB1E is a language I, (Adnan), have made. It can be pronounced in several ways, like **Osabie**, **Osable**, **Zero-five A B one E**. They are all correct since there is no actual way to pronounce the language. The name itself has a deeper meaning. When interpreted as a hexadecimal number, converting this number to *Base64* would result into: **Base**.

Comment: You forgot to mention O 5 A B 1 E.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Ayy Lmao or Ayy LeMeow?

Comment: Also, 05AB1E contains BA5E.

Answer (score 12):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix)

Click on any snippet's header to try it in the [online interpreter](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix)!

For reference, **the text in bold tells you the important stuff.**

#### Factoid

Cubix is a stack-based language, created by me, which runs like a 2D language such as Befunge. The main difference? **The code is run on the outside of a cube.**

#### [Length 1](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=QA==&speed=4)

```
@
```

This is pretty much the character most commonly used. Why? Because **it immediately ends execution of the program.** In fact, it's the only way to end the program.

This is useless as a program, though, because it gets turned into this cube:

```
   @
>. . . .
   .
```

Where the IP (instruction pointer) is started at the arrow, and `.` is a no-op. This just loops around forever. Take a good look and you'll see why *every* possible 1-byte program never ends (or does anything at all).

#### [Length 2](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=Lk8=&speed=4)

```
.O
```

Now that we've gotten over the length-1 barrier, we can finally see some output! Here's the cube net:

```
   .
>O . . .
   .
```

where the IP starts at the arrow. **`O` takes the TOS (top-of-stack) and outputs it as a number.** If the stack is empty (e.g. at the beginning of the program), this prints `0`.

When the IP gets over to the right edge of the above cube-net, it wraps back around to the left edge, onto the `O` again. Thus, this program prints `0` forever.

#### [Length 3](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=QE8v&speed=4)

```
@O/
```

Our first <s>cheerleader</s> program that terminates! This gets mapped to the following net:

```
   @
>O / . .
   .
```

where the IP starts at the arrow. As we've seen before, the `O` prints the TOS, which is currently `0`, as a number. Next comes a new character: `/`. This is a mirror. There are five different mirrors: `/`, `\`, `|`, `_`, and `T`. **Mirrors reflect the IP from one direction to another.**

When the IP hits this mirror, it is redirected to the north. This puts it on the top face, which is `@`. Thus, the program is terminated, and the output is `0`.

#### [Length 4](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=QElvXg==&input=NjU=&speed=4)

```
@Io^
```

This expands into the following cube net:

```
   @
>I o ^ .
   .
```

A bunch of new characters here:

- The first character is `I`, which **inputs an integer from STDIN**.
- Next comes `o`. This is like `O`, but **outputs a char-code** instead of an integer.
- After that, we see `^`. This is one of four arrows: `^`, `>`, `v`, and `<`. **Arrows point the IP in a specific direction.** `^` points the IP north, where it hits the `@` and terminates.

#### [Length 5](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=QGk/b18=&input=SGVsbG8h&speed=4)

```
@i?o_
```

Finally a (somewhat) useful program. This expands into the following cube net:

```
   @
>i ? o _
   .
```

This is a `cat` program: it prints the entirety of the input, one char at a time.

The first character is `i`, which **inputs a char-code from STDIN**. If there's nothing in STDIN, it pushes `-1`.

Next comes `?`. This is one of the most useful chars: **it redirects the IP based on the sign of the TOS.** If the TOS is negative, the IP turns left; if the TOS is positive, the IP turns right; if the TOS is zero, the IP continues in the same direction.

The combination of these chars does the following:

- If the input is a null byte, the IP continues straight, outputting with `o` and wrapping back around to the `i`. (The `_` is a mirror which does nothing when the IP is traveling east-west.)
- If the input is anything else, the IP turns right, wrapping around to the bottom and hitting the `_`. This turns it around; it goes back across the bottom and hits the `?` again, turning right. This time, though, it's sent through the `o` and back around to the `i`.
- If there is no more input, the IP turns left, hits `@`, and ends the program.

#### [Length 6](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=OU8vOylv&speed=4)

```
9O/;)o
```

Our first happy program! `;)` This expands into the following cube net:

```
   9
>O / ; )
   o
```

The first character is `O`, which prints the TOS (currently `0`). Then the IP hits a mirror `/` which redirects it over the top face onto the `9`. **Digits push themselves to the stack.** Note that they do not concatenate; `12` pushes a `1` and a `2`.

So now the TOS is `9`. The IP comes down on the other side of the cube and hits the `)`, which **increments the TOS by 1.** Now the TOS is 10, which tells the `o` on the bottom face to output a newline.

The IP comes up and hits the mirror again, turning to the east. The next character it hits is the `;`, which **pops the TOS (removes it).** The stack is now back to its natural state with infinite `0`s.

Next is the `)`, which increments the TOS to 1. Now the IP is back at the start of the program, except the TOS is now `1` instead of `0`. Can you figure out what this program does?

---

Feel free to add more interesting snippets!

Comment: nice to see you back

Comment: ... and you've implemented the additional stack operations :)

Comment: @MickyT Thanks :) Indeed I have, have fun with them!

Comment: +1 from me. I recently saw your [print all integers answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/93536/52210) and was intrigued by your language and looking forward to see more. In addition, it reminds me of an unfolded Rubik's Cube, and as a [twisty puzzle collector](http://twistypuzzles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=26889) I can really appreciate that from a personal view. :) Hexagony and Cubix are currently my top two languages to learn one day, as soon as I have a bit more free time on my hands.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thank you very much! I like Hexagony very much as well; it was the main inspiration for Cubix. Seeing as you like twisty puzzles, I should tell you that I'm planning to add commands to actually manipulate the program as if twisting a Rubik's cube, which you may find interesting. :)

Answer (score 11):

## Python 3

**Factoid**
Python 3 has many major syntax changes from Python 2. Because of this, Python 3 is not always directly backwards-compatible with Python 2 (although a couple of edits could make it that way). Currently, Python 3 is at version 3.4. I will be using this version.
**1-length code**
`1`
Numbers above 0 and strings containing characters themselves count as True.
**2-length code**
`''`
This is the empty string. It counts as False.
**3-length code**
`l=3`
This assigns the variable `l` with the value 3.
**4-length code**
`1+45`
If you're running this in Python's interactive shell, you'll get 46. Why? Because in Python's shell, doing math will automatically print it. Don't believe me? Install and run Python 3 without a file, then type the snippet.
**Length 5**
`l=[1]`
This is a list with one item - `1`. That's all you need to make a list - but there are some other ways.

Comment: But Python 2 **IS** forward compatible with Python 3.

Comment: Nope. In Python 3 (at least 3.3), `print` has been changed from a statement to a function. That's the big one that affects all non-version-neutral code. The rest of the changes are found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html).

Comment: I already included the `print` statement/function in my showcase of Python.

Comment: Also, there's `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: @mbomb007 OK. Thanks for letting me know. Should I change my programming language?

Comment: Probably, since there's already 2 Python showcases, not including this one. Feel free to suggest some Python 3 snippets to Sp3000, since his has fewer snippets.

Comment: @mbomb007 Thanks. One last question- do I edit this post, retaining the votes, or do I make a new one?

Comment: I've actually got snippets lined up if the votes ever come in :P But in any case I think it's better to keep this - you can always try and feature different things if you ever get more votes. Editing wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @Sp3000 OK. I have a backup language just in case, I'll use that. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

## TI-99/4 GPL byte codes

#### Factoid:

GPL stands for Graphics Programming Language. It is a byte-wise interpreted language that is found in GROMs in both the console and cartridges. GROMs are 6k ROMs with an internal 16-bit address counter. The upper three bits determine which GROM will respond. Most instructions can access CPU memory or video memory with ease. Which is important as the console only has 256 bytes of CPU RAM. It was introduced on the TI-99/4 in 1979 and also used on the TI-99/4A.

Note: All bytes and addresses are in hexadecimal.

#### Length 1:

```
03   ; SCAN
```

This will scan the keyboard and/or joysticks using the mode found in CPU byte 8374 and place the scan code in 8375. Joystick displacements may be placed in 8376 (x) and 8377 (y), depending on the mode.

#### Length 2:

```
07 20    ; ALL ' '
```

This will fill the first 768 (32x24) bytes of video memory with spaces. In the default video memory layout, this fills the entire screen with the given character. No provisions are made for different layouts or 40 column mode which uses 960 (40x24) bytes. The TMS9918A Video Display Processor (vdp) can place the screen on 1K boundaries and the character definitions on 2K boundaries. To maximize space for tokens and variables, BASIC places both of these overlapping at the beginning of the 16K video memory. This makes the first 96 character definitions unusable, so BASIC has a bias added to the ascii values on the screen. Provisions are made in several rom routines to accommodate this bias.

#### Length 3:

```
95 A1 23    ; DINCT V@0123
```

This adds 2 to video memory word 0123. A word on the TI is 2 bytes, msb first. Most instructions can operate on a byte or word, in video and/or CPU memory. For video memory addresses from 0F00 to 3FFF, the encoding takes one more byte. Address encoding can get quite involved, including indirection and indexing.

#### Length 4:

```
A0 A1 23 10    ; ADD @8310, V@0123
```

This adds CPU byte 8310 to video memory byte 0123. For CPU addresses 8300 to 837F, the encoding only takes 1 byte. Also, all CPU addresses have a bias of 8300 added to the encoded value. This is because the fast 256 bytes of CPU ram is at 83xx. For two operand instructions, like this, the destination is encoded first.

#### Length 5:

```
08       ; FMT
21 48 49 ; VTEX 'HI'
FB       ; FEND
```

This will draw the string 'HI' vertically at the current display location, stored in CPU byte 837E (row) and 837F (col). GPL has an alternate interpreter known as the format sub-interpreter. The first and last lines enter and exit the sub-interpreter, respectively. Most of the FMT commands use the lower 5 bits of the opcode as a count, 1 to 32, encoded as one less than the count.

#### Length 6:

```
30 10 A0 00 80 00    ; MOVE @8310, G@8000, V@0000
```

This will move the number of bytes in CPU word 8310 from GROM address 8000 to the beginning of video memory. Move is possibly the most powerful GPL command. It can use GROM address space as source or destination, in addition to using the usual address encoding. It can also use the read only video controller registers as a destination.

#### Length 7:

```
06 00 34 ; CALL BEEP
03       ; L1: SCAN
40 13    ; BR L1
0B       ; EXIT
```

Now we have a real program that beeps once, waits for a key, and then resets the console. TI defined several fixed entry points for GPL calls such as BEEP, which plays a 1397 Hz tone for 200 ms. SCAN was used in the length 1 snippet. It also returns the condition (cnd) bit set if a new key was detected. BR *B*ranches to the label if the cnd bit is *R*eset. Individual GROMs are 6K bytes on 8K boundaries and the BR and BS (*B*ranch if cnd is *S*et) instructions are limited to targets in the current GROM. Cartridges are given complete control over the console, so an EXIT resets back to the power on screen.

#### Length 8:

```
0F 17    ; COSX2: XML VPUSH
0F 0D    ; XML SMUL
06 00 2C ; CALL COS
00       ; RTN
```

This makes a subroutine that returns cos(x<sup>2</sup>). Where the input and output are the floating point value in CPU ram 834A. XML is e*X*ecute *M*achine *L*anguage procedure. The second byte of the XML instruction defines the table (upper nibble) and index in that table (lower nibble) to get the address to execute. The first two tables (0x and 1x) are predefined in rom. VPUSH pushes the float at 834A onto the floating point stack in video memory. SMUL multiplies the float at 834A with the top of the floating point stack. COS calculates the cosine of the float at 834A (in radians). RTN returns back to the caller. The TI floating point format is 8 bytes with the first byte the exponent and the remaining 7 bytes are base 100 digits. This yields 14 decimal digits of precision. Not bad for 1979.

#### Length 9:

```
07 20                 ; ALL ' '
35 00 C0 A3 00 A2 FF  ; MOVE 192, V@02FF, V@0300
```

This is what is needed to clear the screen in 40 column mode as noted in the length 2 snippet. This assumes that the screen is at the beginning of the video memory. The move copies the last byte filled by ALL to the remainder of the screen. This trick to fill memory by setting the move destination one more than the source is used in the TI GROMs quite a bit. Here we see move with an immediate count showing how flexible this instruction can be. Also, note that the built-in BASIC cannot use 40 column mode because of the video memory layout mentioned in the length 2 snippet. Extended BASIC with the expansion ram can use all of the video memory for video.

#### Length 10:

```
0E C2     ; PARS >C2
83 4A     ; DNEG @834A
C6 4C 63  ; CH 99, @834C
76 71     ; BS 5671
10        ; CONT
```

This is an actual snippet from the built-in BASIC GROM called when an unary minus token is encountered. PARS and CONT are GPL commands that are only used by BASIC. PARS parses BASIC tokens until it reaches a token that is smaller than the value given. CONT continues the BASIC interpreter. The TI floating point format indicates a negative value by negating the first word. CPU address 834A is the current floating point value as mentioned in the length 8 snippet. CH sets the cnd bit if the destination is larger (unsigned comparison) than the source. BS jumps to GROM address 5671 to display an error message if the byte at CPU address 834C is greater than 99. This is the second base 100 digit of the floating point value. Since BASIC is written in GPL and GPL is also interpreted, the BASIC interpreter is painfully slow.

#### Length 11:

```
02 FF       ; RAND 255
BC B0 00 78 ; ST @8378, V*8300
91 00       ; DINC @8300
90 78       ; INC @8378
01          ; RTNC
```

This is a routine that places a random byte at video memory pointed to by CPU word 8300, increments the pointer, then returns the cnd bit set if the number was 255. RAND n puts a random number between 0 and n into CPU byte 8378. ST copies that byte to video memory. V*8300 indicates indirection into video memory, but all pointers can only be in CPU memory.  DINC increments a word. INC increments a byte and sets the cnd bit if the result is zero. RTNC returns from the routine without clearing the cnd bit. Normally, calls, returns, and branches clear the cnd bit. This feature can be used to create a fixed entry point table using BR which is a byte smaller than B (unconditional branch). This was used by TI as mentioned in the length 7 snippet.

Answer (score 11):

## Treehugger

[Treehugger](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Treehugger) is an interesting Brainf*** variant which operates on a downwards-infinite binary tree of byte values instead of on a rightwards-infinite tape. In addition to Brainf***'s 8 commands (two of which have been slightly redefined), it adds a ninth command, which will serve as my length 1 snippet.

A web interpreter can be found [here.](http://codepen.io/AndoDaan/full/yyaxJP)

**Length 1 snippet:** `^`

The new command (although, in a literal Brainf***-to-Treehugger translation, it can be treated as equivalent to Brainf*** `<` instruction). Moves one position up the tree.

**Length 2 snippet:** `<>`

`<` moves one position down the current node's left branch, `>` moves one position down the current node's right branch. Thus, this will move the data pointer as shown here:

[image]

**Length 3 snippet:** `+[]`

An infinite loop, exactly like in Brainf***.

**Length 5 snippet:** `,[.,]`

Another loaner from Brainf***: a cat program.

Answer (score 11):

## [Golfical](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Golfical)

Golfical is a shiny, brand-new graphical programming language I made over the past few days, and published earlier today.

It uses a stack, a tape, and a register as memory. But primarily the tape.

The included encoder utility can be used to compress programs into a raw binary form, which can then be converted back to the original image or run directly by adding the `-x` flag. This requires from one to three bytes for each pixel, plus three bytes extra for encoding the dimensions (length and width are encoded as 
twelve bits each, just in case 8 isn't enough for some reason.)

Of course, the encoding is somewhat lossy, as all other colors that don't have instructions assigned to them are changed to white (both to save space and because the specs guarantee that no instruction will ever be assigned to white.)

**One pixel example:**

[image]

Magnified 200x, with color labels:

[image]

When the red channel is zero, Golfical interprets the green and blue channels as an integer literal and stores it in the target of the pointer. Thus, this stores the value 255*256+255=65535 into the target of the pointer. This is the largest number that can be stored directly in this way, though cells can be set in longer ways to values as large as 2<sup>31</sup>-1.

In the binary encoding generated by the included Encoder utility, this would represented by three bytes; the encoding includes an optimization that allows only two bytes to be used for this instruction when the green channel is zero.

**Two pixel example:**

[image]

Magnified 160x with color labels:

[image]

(10,0,0) inputs a number and (10,1,1) outputs it as a character. In the compressed binary encoding, these two instructions add one byte each.

**Three pixel example:**

[image]

Magnified 160x, with color labels:

[image]

(10,0,1) is like (10,0,0), except it reads a character instead of a number. (12,0,0) pushes the target of the pointer to the stack. (The binary encoding represents these instructions as 1 byte each.)

Therefore, this snippet reads a character, pushes it to the stack, and then reads another character.

**Four pixel example:**

[image]

Magnified 125x, with color labels:

[image]

Simulates the rolling of a d100. The two new instructions here are 02xxxx (which works like 00xxxx but as an increment instead of an assignment) and 0D0001 (13,0,1) which sets the target of the pointer to a random integer between 0, inclusive, and its previous value, exclusive. Like 00xxxx, 02xxxx is represented in the encoding using two bytes if the green channel is zero or three otherwise. 0D0001 is represented as one byte.

**Five pixel example:**

It took me a while to decide what to do with this one, but eventually I decided to go with this:

[image]

Magnified 125x, with color labels:

[image]

(11,0,0) through (11,0,3) are absolute turn instructions (relative turn instructions, as well as many of the conditional relative turns, are later in the 11 block). (11,0,1) is East and (11,0,3) is West.

This program prints `lolololololololololololololololololo` ad infininum.

**Six Pixel Example**

[image]

Magnified 200x, with color labels:

[image]

An infinite counter (limited, of course, by the 32-bit two's complement integer range; a proper infinite counter would be much harder to implement.) Also our first properly 2-dimensional example here.

**Eight pixel example:**

[image]

Magnified 100x with color labels:

[image]

A primality tester using the language's prime testing builtin (14,3,0), which makes a relative right turn if and only if the target of the pointer is prime. The official encoder program encodes this program in 13 bytes.

Comment: Example one, please?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Here you go.

Answer (score 11):

## [ForceLang](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/ForceLang)

ForceLang (name proposed by TanMath) is a programming language I published on January 12.

Functionality includes arbitrary-precision rational numbers, both console and GUI IO, and file input (file output has not yet been added, but will likely be added later)

Control flow is currently handled using gotoes, evaluated gotoes, and conditionals.

**Length 1 snippet:** `0`

A number literal for the rational number `0/1`.

**Length 2 snippet**: `io`

The `io` namespace contains the language's console and file IO functionality. GUI IO is located in a separate namespace.

**Length 3 snippet:** `nil`

A constant field containing the null reference.

**Length 4 snippet:** `0xFF`

A *hexadecimal* number literal for the rational number `255/1` (hexadecimal literals can only be used for integers).

Hex literals are useful as color codes for the language's (currently somewhat limited) graphics library.

**Length 5 snippet:** `11/13`

A number literal for the rational number 11/13, which is stored exactly as a BigRational.

**Length 6 snippet:** `!!TRUE`

Obviously, this returns TRUE.

**Length 7 snippet:** `def a a`

An abuse of the `def` instruction that causes any subsequent attempts to evaluate the expression `a` to result in an infinite loop.

**Length 8 snippet:** `gui.show`

A method that produces a simple gui alert.

**Length 9 snippet:** `math.sqrt`

Estimates the square root of a number as another BigRational. It does this by doing some math to find an integer which approximates this value, then applying four iterations of the Babylonian Method to this initial approximation.

**Length 11 snippet:** `random.rand`

The function `random.rand` can be used to produce random numbers on `[0, (2^m-1)/(2^m)]` for arbitrary positive integer values of `m` (effectively on `[0,1)` as `m` becomes large). When called with no arguments (`random.rand()`) it uses `m=80`.

---

Some other answers in this language:

- [Count Up Forever](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63834/count-up-forever/74435#74435)
- [Smallest base-10 integer that can be printed by a program shorter than itself](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67921/what-is-the-smallest-positive-base-10-integer-that-can-be-printed-by-a-program-s/75062#75062)
- ["Hello, World!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world/74433#74433)

Comment: We need two more snippets :)

Answer (score 11):

## [Factor](http://factorcode.org)

**Factor** is a concatenative, stack-oriented and object-functional programming language first developed by Slava Pestov in 2003 as a *scripting* language for a game engine. Factor unites the simplicity and durability of Forth's stack-procedural paradigm and extensible word-based syntax, with the applicative, point-free and functional styles of Joy and Lisp.

In Factor, whitespace is the `apply` operator, the default operation. All words are first class objects; in fact, almost everything is a first-class object which means tons of possibility for extensible syntax, new types and literals, and all the other awesomeness introduced by [Homoiconicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity).

Unlike Forth, Factor prefers to use the many, many different higher-order words at its disposal over shuffle words, which should be avoided for the sake of readability and idiomaticity.

You can [download a Factor binary](http://factorcode.org), or [find Factor in active development on GitHub](http://github.com/factor/factor).

Oh, its [documentation](http://docs.factorcode.org) is amazing, and the Listener UI / IDE (written in pure Factor) has the documentation offline and searchable. :D

I mentioned above that Factor was a scripting language -- that was back when it ran on the JVM, too. Factor, its runtime and its optimising native-code compiler are 97% pure Factor, with just 3% being low-level C++ for the VM and bootstrap.

<sup><sup>I guess we'll go top-to-bottom, Iunno.</sup></sup>

<sup>[Link to this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76437/46231), [Link to Edit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/76437/edit).</sup>

#### Length 1

For length 1, let's start at the most basic building block of Factor: the word that lets us make more words.

[Factor's pretty verbose](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75610) so there's not much to do with one byte, because the "words" are literally *words*, and there's a lot of whitespace everywhere.

This means the fun in golfing comes not from shortening identifiers, but from re-**Factor**ing, which is where Factor gets its name. :D

Factor gets a lot of its pleasant syntax from Forth. The simplest flavour of [word-definition word, `:`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-__colon__,syntax.html) is an example.

Use it like:

```
: word-name ( input -- output ) word-body ;
```

The word will then be callable by `word-name`, and `word-body` will execute, taking and putting things to and from the stack. `word-name`'s stack effect *must* match its actual effect on the stack. If `add` takes two numbers from the stack and adds them together, leaving the result on the stack,

```
: add ( a b -- x ) + ;
```

Then its stack effect is that of the only word in its body (part of the power of concatenative languages). The identifiers in the effect don't matter, just that they are a proper representation.

#### Length 2

Another word-definition word, [`::`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-__colon____colon__,locals.html), allows the use of the [`:>`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-__colon____gt__,locals.html) lexical-variable-binding word, and causes inputs to be bound to the names in the stack effect.

```
:: join-strings ( a b -- x ) a b suffix! ;
```

To bind a value to a name:

```
:: var-demo ( a b c -- ) a c + b * sqrt :> val ;
```

`val` goes out of scope when the word is done executing.

#### Length 3

```
[ ]
```

Here, I'll let you have a guess at what this is. Hint: It's not an array.

---

You don't know?
It's a [quotation](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-%5B,syntax.html) -- it allows putting an executable block of literal code on the stack, that the higher-order functional and applicative words can manipulate.

Brackets for blocks come from Smalltalk syntax (with the `locals` vocabulary you also get `[| param | code ]` which kind of resembles Smalltalk's `[ :param | code ]`).

#### Length 4

I'll try to do something more interesting this time, as fede s. suggested in the comments:

```
2bi@
```

Before I explain what this is, I should probably first explain something about Factor identifiers.

A valid Factor identifier is any string which matches the following:

```
^[^"][^\s]+$
```

Yes, that's it. Any identifier can contain any character that isn't whitespace, and it can't begin with one or more `"`s, because strings are special to the lexer. It can have `"` elsewhere within it, though.

The NUL byte, the character at UTF8 888 and the byte at 127, ASCII DEL are all valid identifiers. For portability, sometimes `SYMBOL`s may be stripped of their non-ASCII bytes (Windows, for instance).

This may be rather shocking to the C people and the Python people (and even the Lisp people, who allow some nice stuff in names), but fear not, for you will come to like it.

So `2bi@` is just one identifier, one name for one function. But what does it do? Well, the [`bi@`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-bi,kernel.html) function applies one quotation to two items on the stack:

```
"5" "10" [ string>number ] bi@

--- Data stack:
5 
10
```

(bi stands for [bifurcate](http://google.com/search?q=define:bifurcate), if you were curious.)

```
"5" "10" "15" "20" [ append string>number ] 2bi@

--- Data stack:
510
1520
```

[`2bi@`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-2bi__at__,kernel.html), like `2map`, takes a quotation with stack effect `( obj1 obj2 -- ... )`, which gets applied first to `w` and `x`, then `y` and `z` in pairs.

#### Length 5

Finally, a word for working with sequences. Factor is no APL / J / K / Octave / what have you, but its array processing skills are... close... kinda.

```
union
```

If you're familar with Python (like I am), then you may recognise this better as the `|` operator on `set`s:

```
{ 1 2 3 } { 2 3 4 } union

--- Data stack:
{ 1 2 3 4 }
```

Removes duplicates while performing element-wise OR. Technically, the [`union`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-union,sets.html) word is from the [`sets`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-sets.html) vocabulary and not the `sequences` vocab. This is because, like Python, sets are special, super-fast immutable sequences that don't allow duplicate entries.

Also much like Python, any sequence (byte vector, hashtable, set, etc) that implements the [Sequence protocol](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-sequence-protocol.html) (`__iter__` being the equivalent in Python) is considered fair game and supports a well-defined set (hah) of operations, so any word that works on a generic sequence A will also work on a generic set B if both have the right method dispatch.

#### Length 6

Ooh, more arrays! (Note that arrays are immutable; all operations on them yield new arrays and the old ones are GC'd. Vectors are mutable and slower, but we'll cross that bridge when we get there.)

```
2array
```

This is a *highly* useful word. Any guess at what it does? Here:

```
IN: scratchpad 1 2 2array

--- Data stack:
{ 1 2 } 

IN: scratchpad { 3 4 } 2array

--- Data stack:
{ { 1 2 } { 3 4 } }
```

Well shucks, it takes **two** things off the stack and makes a new array from them. `1array`, `3array` and `4array` all do *exactly* what you'd expect, and `narray` takes an arbitrary `n` argument, to avoid messy concatenation code.

If I may digress yet again about naming...

In Java or Python, one might call this function `values2array` or `valuesToArray` or even `values2Array`. However, here in Factor-land, we have some [conventions](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-conventions.html).

Remember my spiel about identifiers? Numeric digits in names should only be used for indicating real numbers or counts of things; in particular, this means `2array` should not be read as `to-array` but as `two-array`.

The word which does `to-array` is called `>array`. The word which turns a number to a string is `number>string`, and the word which turns an object's slots to an array is `tuple>array`. See a pattern? Hmm.

Users of [Racket](http://racket-lang.org) will feel right at home with these sorts of names, since Racket uses stuff like `number->string`.

Comment: @fedes. Done! Have a suggestion for #5? You can even edit it in yourself; I'll make sure to accept it :P

Comment: Hey, for #6, how about the `2`/`3`/`4array` words?

Comment: Also, for #1, it might be better to mention `.` (i.e. the prettyprinter)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Sounds good, I'll go with `2array` and mention the others. Sorry, but I *really* don't think `.` is nearly as important as `:`, and `:` is pretty distinct (and ties to Forth, from which Factor gets a lot).

Comment: @fedes. Hmmm, I like `union` :D

Comment: @cat Oh, fair enough. I forgot that FORTH was a thing too. Oh, and idea for 7, when you have that many votes: [`with-ui`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-with-ui%2Cui.html). It's how you do GUIs in Factor! Or part of it, at least.

Comment: On the naming conventions and Racket (actually from scheme), there's also `-` for separating words (map-index), `!` for mutators (union!) and `?` for predicates and tests (odd?)! Good choice IMHO :D

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Good thought!

Comment: @fedes. Yes ^~^ That's why I linked to the doc, I didn't wanna ramble *too* long.

Comment: Why did someone just downvote this??

Comment: Also WTF w/downvote? Someone pushing another language higher? ಠ~ಠ

Comment: @fedes. I don't know why I didn't see the notification for those comments, but you are the Smalltalkist (Smalltalk-er? Smalltalk expert) here, so you should be the one to edit that trivia in :P

Comment: @cat, added the bit (check I didn't mess anything up!). Here's something cute about identifiers: `[ [ "42" create-in ] with-compilation-unit ] ignore-errors` `[ \ 42 [ "Life, the Universe and Everything" ] ( -- s ) define-declared ] with-compilation-unit` `42`. I almost added it, but that part's already a bit long, so better leave as comment!

Comment: @fedes. I... what... that's *freaking* amazing!

Comment: @fedes. Well, your suggested edit got rejected as too deviant (unsurprisingly) but I've added it for you :)

Comment: Thanks for edit! ;) You can also `set` numbers, that's what made me look for a way to define them too. I thought you'd like it!

Comment: You owe us a few more snippets!

Answer (score 11):

## Octave

**Note:**

I got to say hello to a little [earthling](http://rlv.zcache.com/greetings_earthling_baby_creeper-r369cc620aa6748f4818ed1da2f7d60c0_jfhfi_324.jpg) in the delivery room a few weeks back. Although she's lighter than [a ball](https://www.xxl.no/mam/celum/celum_assets/9131025170462_1117770-_BLACK-WHITE_146658_jpg.jpg?1), she takes up quite a lot of my time. I'll redirect my focus to more important things (for instance showing of the awesomeness of Octave) when I have some spare time. Until then, please have some patience =)

---

Octave and MATLAB are very similar, and many of the nice features [flawr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24877/flawr) has showcased would be good showcases for Octave as well. I will try to avoid reusing any of the material flawr has [already used](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44702/31516).

**Snippet 1:**

```
.
```

A full stop punctuation is a very versatile operator, and helps solve a lot of tasks very elegant:

- [Element-wise operations](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Arithmetic-Ops.html): `a.*b` (equvalent to `times(a,b)`)
- [Transpose](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Arithmetic-Ops.html#XREFtranspose): `a.'` (equivalent to `transpose(a)`)

  - Using only `'` gives the complex conjugated transpose (equivalent to `ctranspose(a)`)
- [Short hand notation for creating and accessing structs:](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Structure-Arrays.html) `a.b` (equvalent to `struct(a,b)`
- Decimal point, of course: `314/100`, `3.14`, and `.314e1` are all the same.

**Snippet 2:**

```
++
```

[Increment operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Increment-Ops.html) are one of the great features in Octave, that doesn't exist in MATLAB. It's known to most programmers as languages such as C++, Java, JavaScript, PHP and Perl all support it. Nevertheless, it's awesome when golfing, and often makes Octave submissions a bit more competitive than MATLAB. `x++` is 2 bytes shorter than `x=x+1`.

**Snippets 3:**

Edit: 02.05.2016 - I'll get to this ASAP!

**Snippet 4:**

```
a+a'
```

This is a great way to create a grid of values, similar to `meshgrid` in MATLAB.

```
a = 0:3;
a+a'
ans =    
   0   1   2   3
   1   2   3   4
   2   3   4   5
   3   4   5   6
```

You can of course use this with vectors of different lengths. `a+b'` produces the same result as:

```
bsxfun(@plus,a,b')
```

**Snippet 5:**

```
a=b=1
```

In Octave, you assign a value to several variables at the same time. The MATLAB equivalent is 7 bytes: `a=1;b=1`

**Snippet 6:**

Edit: 02.05.2016: Octave is way better than MATLAB for golfing. More snippets = More possibilities to demonstrate. I'll get to this ASAP!

**Factoid:**

Octave is known to most as a free alternative to Mathwork's MATLAB. Octave was originally conceived (in about 1988) to be companion software for an undergraduate-level textbook on chemical reactor design[<sup>1</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave)

The name has nothing to do with music, but is actually the name of one of the author's former professors who wrote a famous textbook on chemical reaction engineering, and who was also well known for his ability to do quick "back of the envelope" calculations.[<sup>2</sup>](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/about.html).

Answer (score 11):

## [Ouroboros](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Ouroboros)

Each line of an Ouroboros program represents a [snake eating its own tail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros), with the beginning of the line being the head and the end being the tail. The only control flow operations are commands to eat or regurgitate characters of the tail. When the instruction pointer reaches the last part of the line that hasn't been eaten, it loops back to the beginning. To stop execution, simply swallow the instruction pointer.

#### Factoid

Ouroboros has a [Stack Snippet interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61624/16766).

#### Length 1

```
n
```

Outputs the top of the stack as a number. An empty stack is treated as if it contained infinite zeros, so this outputs `0`. No characters are ever eaten, so the program loops (and prints) infinitely.

#### Length 2

```
1(
```

Pushes a `1` and then uses `(` to eat that many characters from the end of the snake. This means eating the last character. However, since that's where the instruction pointer currently is, the snake dies and the program terminates.

The program would also terminate if the number were `2`, or indeed any larger number; in that case the entire snake would be swallowed. (Physically impossible, but hey--this is a metaphor.)

#### Length 3

```
32n
```

Although Ouroboros processes one character per tick, it still supports multi-digit numbers in the expected way. This program will push and output `32` infinitely (rather than, for instance, pushing `3`, pushing `2`, and outputting only the `2`).

One interesting side effect: a multi-digit number is recognized as such even when it bridges the end of the snake. The code `2n3` will first output `2`, but thereafter will output `32` infinitely.

#### Length 4

```
rnao
```

`r` reads a positive integer from input, grabbing all contiguous digits until it finds a non-digit. `n` outputs as a number. `a` pushes `10`, and `o` outputs this as a character (newline). Thus, an input of `1 2.3 -4abc55` will yield

```
1
2
3
4
55
```

However, because this snippet doesn't terminate the loop when the input is used up, the program will continue: `r` will start giving `-1`s to signal end-of-input, and `n` will keep outputting them indefinitely.

#### Length 5

```
n?2*(
```

Prints one or more `0`s, with the exact count depending on random numbers.

`n` behaves as in snippet 1, outputting a `0` from the empty stack. `?2*` generates a random floating-point number between 0 and 1 and doubles it. Then `(` eats that many characters (rounded down). Thus, if `?` generated a number >= 0.5, the program halts; if not, it loops, prints another `0`, etc.

#### Length 6

```
"oooo(
```

`"` toggles between executing characters and treating them as a string. As in other 2D languages, you can define a string using only one quote mark because the instruction pointer wraps around. A key difference with Ouroboros, however, is that the string is pushed in reverse order, so that the first character is on the top of the stack. This means we don't need to write strings backwards or have a stack-reverse operator like ><> does.

The above code pushes `"oooo("` and outputs the first four characters (the `o`s). It then uses the last number remaining on the stack (`40`, the charcode of `(`) as the argument to the `(` command. Eating 40 characters definitely swallows the IP, and the program halts.

#### Length 7

```
r.*.n!(
```

[Truth machine program.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62785/16766)

`r` reads a number from input, or -1 for EOF. `.*` multiplies it by itself, keeping 0 and 1 the same but mapping -1 to 1. `.n` dups and outputs the number. Finally, `!(` logically negates and  eats that many characters of the end of the snake. If the number was `0`, this eats the `(` and dies. If the number was `1`, this eats zero characters, and execution loops back to the beginning of the snake, printing `1` indefinitely.

#### Length 8

```
i.0<2*(o
```

Cat program.

`i` reads a single character from input, pushing its charcode (or -1 on EOF). `.0<` duplicates and tests if the value was less than 0; i.e., pushes 1 on EOF and 0 otherwise. `2*(` multiplies by 2 and swallows that many characters. On EOF, this eats `(o` and ends the program; otherwise, nothing is eaten, and `o` outputs the character from input. The snake then loops back to the beginning.

In writing this snippet, I realized that cat [can actually be done in four characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62379/16766): `i.)o`. Go read the explanation on that answer for some crazy abuse of undefined behavior.

*(Length 9 snippet pending)*

#### Length 10

```
.!+.@.nao+
```

Outputs the Fibonacci sequence, starting from 0 and continuing indefinitely.

First, we need to initialize the stack by pushing a `1`. The trouble is that any initialization code at the head of a snake will run *every* time through (since it's at the head, we have no way of eating it). Therefore `.!+` is designed to turn the top of the stack into a `1` iff it was previously `0` (which is the case when the stack is empty). `.!` dups and logically negates (`1` if the value was `0`, otherwise `0`), and `+` adds that result to the top value.

(For a version that uses a second snake to perform the initialization, see the GitHub readme.)

Now the bulk of the program. Call the two numbers on the stack `x` and `y`, where `x` is smaller and `y` is on the top of the stack. `.@.n` copies `y`, rotates `x` to the top, and outputs a copy of it. `ao` outputs a newline (as in snippet 4), and `+` adds `x` to a copy of `y`. Now the stack contains `y` and `x+y`, and we proceed to the next iteration.

Answer (score 11):

## Batch

#### Factoid

Batch uses commands that the Windows command line uses. A bunch of these were inherited from the (ancient) MS-DOS.

#### Length 1

```
:
```

This creates an empty label.  In Batch, empty labels are perfectly legal, even if they don't do anything.

#### Length 2

```
at
```

This command schedules commands and programs to be run at a specified time. The batch file must be granted elevated administrator privileges for this to work.

#### Length 3

```
rem
```

A command that discards parameters supplied after it. This essentially comments out text.

#### Length 4

```
echo
```

With four characters, we can finally print text! This will print out whatever comes after it.

#### Length 5

```
start
```

As one of the most simple commands, this just opens up a separate command-prompt window. Nothing too complicated about this at all.

#### Length 6

```
chkdsk
```

This command also requires elevated administrator privileges. This command is short for "check disk". It does what it says; it checks a disk and provides a status report.

#### Length 7

```
replace
```

This command is used to replace one file with another. The file names are passed as parameters to the command.

#### Length 8

```
shutdown
```

This command can shutdown your computer. It has a variety of parameters, and like setting shutdown time, a shutdown comment, or aborting the shutdown.

Comment: Length 9: BITSADMIN...

Answer (score 11):

## Pascal

***Factoid*** : Pascal programming language is a very old programming language
which is invented in 1970 (2 years older than C) by Professor Niklaus Wirth .
Original Pascal is procedural .

Because of its easy syntax and perfect efficiency , many programs have been made using Pascal . some examples are :*TeX - Apple Lisa - Total Commender - Skype*

Major Implementations are : *Gnu Pascal - Free Pascal - Turbo Pascal - Borland Pascal*

---

### Length 1 snippet :

```pascal
.
```

This is a dot ! Any pascal program must end with "." even if it is possible to be terminated in the middle . This dot is usually written after an `end` .
To terminate the program somewhere at the middle of execution , you need to use `halt` command

```pascal
;
```

This is not a snippet  , I've just mentioned it for its importance . this is an empty statement . It is so important to use it in right place . You must put this at the end of almost "every" command . but there are some execptions too . for example :

```pascal
...
IF (x<=y) THEN HALT
...
```

is different from :

```pascal
...
IF (x<=y) THEN HALT ;
...
```

We'll see this difference later .

---

### Length 3 snippet :

```pascal
END
```

This is a reserved word in Pascal . Pascal is a block-structured language - like C - which means a program is separated to blocks , and each block may be separated to some smaller blocks and so on . each block contains some statements . In Pascal , Blocks start with `BEGIN` and end with `END` (like `{` and `}` in C) .
Main program is ended with `END.` and all the sub-programs (like functions , programmer-made procedure etc) are ended with `END;`.

---

### Length 7 snippet:

```pascal
PROGRAM
```

Sorry for the delay, fans! So, this is a `PROGRAM`! Every program must start with `PROGRAM <name>;`, where `<name>` is your program's name. Every program must have a "main block", which is a part of code between `BEGIN` & `END` which is not related to any other parts of code (e.g. it's not a function's definition) & program's execution starts from there.

Comment: “Any pascal program must end with "."” – Not only programs, but units too. “This dot is usually followed by an `end`.” Never seen a `.` followed by `end`, only the reverse. Then `end.` can be followed by any blah-blah, as it is ignored by compiler.

Comment: @manatwork units are not in original pascal and it was first intented in turbo pascal . Also thanks for mentioning that mistake , i'll fix it now

Comment: Oh, so the modern implementations are only mentioned without being compatible with the snippets/explanations. My mistake. (BTW, you misspelled “Borland”.)

Answer (score 11):

### [Your Mom](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/your-mom)

#### Factoid

Your Mom is a stack-based golfing language created because of a mbomb007's chat message on TNB:

> I think someone should create a language called "Your Mom", just so that during an argument over which language is a better one, they can interject that "Your mom is a better language"

<sub>[Source](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30959191#30959191)</sub>

Since Your Mom use Unicode, the length of the snippets are in characters, not bytes

#### Length 1

```
+
```

`+` pop two values and return their sum. Since there is nothing on the stack, the two values are read from stdin.

#### Length 2

```
()
```

Define a empty function. `)` is not needed since it's the end of the program.

#### Length 3

```
#II
```

`#` push a zero, `I` pop the last value, multiply it by 24 and add 18, because Your Mom use base 24. The state of the stack at the end is `[ 450 ]`

#### Length 4

```
¥()@
```

This snippet create a infinite loop.
`¥` push 1 to the stack, `()` define a empty function and `@` pop a function and call it while the element on the top of the stack is true (but don't pop it)

#### Length 5

```
çç#,.
```

This snippet create 2 array (`ç`), push 0 in the last array (`,`) and concatenate the two arrays (`.`)

#### Length 6

```
çÐ,€²Ç
```

This snippet create a array, push to it the user input (`Ð`), define a 1 character function that process the sqare of it's input (`€²`), and map it to the array.

#### Length 7

```
Ð(:_⊟)@
```

This snippet read the user input and print it, and decrement it while it's not 0

#### Length 8

```
##21®€²Ç
```

This snippet create a range from 0 to 20, create a one character function that square it's argument, and map on the range.

Answer (score 10):

## KSFTgolf

I've finally finished at least a very early version of an interpreter for my golfing language KSFTgolf. It probably doesn't work very well, but I'm hoping to make it better by adding instructions that would help to solve problems here. I'll probably be updating it several times while this is posted. I'll try not to break the examples I've already posted. The interpreter is here:

https://github.com/KSFTmh/KSFTgolf

I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with nested loops in the current version of the interpreter. I'll try to fix it, but for now, some of these might not work.

### Length 4

```
r2eu
```

This takes a list of numbers as input and prints the sum of the squares of those numbers. Single-digit numerical literals like `2` push their value, `e` is the exponentiation function, and `u` pops a list and pushes the sum of its elements.

### Length 3

```
trm
```

This prints all of the primes up to 1000. `t` pushes `1000`, and `r` is like a for loop.

### Length 2

```
on
```

This takes a character as input* and prints the ASCII value of it in binary. `o` calls Python's `ord()` function on the top element of the stack, and `n` converts the top element of the stack to binary.

### Length 1

```
m
```

This takes a number as input and prints `1` if the number is prime and `0` otherwise. Input is pushed onto the stack at the beginning of the program and the entire stack is printed at the end.

*It uses Python 2's `input()` function, so string inputs have to be in quotes.

### Factoid

Objects in KSFTgolf don't have types. They're converted whenever they're used.

Comment: I don't know if this is a valid language, but I'm curious about it.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel What do you mean by "valid"?

Comment: Well, there is no documentation. There is only your implementation in python. That is what I meant. But still, I'm curious about it! (Btw, I'm trying to write my own language too (I just get too lazy to write any code). Not a 100% golfing one but can be easily addapted.)

Comment: It will. Also, the documentation will help you to keep track of your progress and goals with the language. A basic documentation might take 2-3 hours to write. But it will be worth it!

Comment: You can write a sloppy documentation, which will take considerably less. But it will look terrible. It's always better to write a good documentation. It shows professionalism and enthusiasm! But yeah, it can take that time. Try it and you'll see I'm right.

Comment: That would be enough. Now, you create a `README.md` file and stuff it there with a title. When people visit it, they will see the documentation. A terrible example can be the language I'm making (there is no real interpreter code there, just examples). You can check here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ismael-miguel/corky-lang/master/README.md and the result is this: https://github.com/ismael-miguel/corky-lang (please, disregard the quality of the content so far.)

Comment: As a side note, you may want to specify if your language is stack based or if the input is stored in a commun (misspelled) place in memory

Comment: On the `README.md` file, on your github. Right in the root of your repository. The file must have that name. You can say for github to create it automatically when you create the repository.

Comment: Oh, sorry my stupidity. You can specify on both places (here and on github). That is useful information to understand how the language works. Popular languages like PHP have their own page and (part of) that information can be skipped. Your language isn't popular (yet). That's why my observation.

Comment: Usually their oficial website. PHP has http://php.net/, Ruby has https://www.ruby-lang.org/, MySQL has http://www.mysql.com/, Python has https://www.python.org/ and many more examples. I hope this is what you are asking, or I will look stupid again.

Comment: That is what I was refering to. They all have their own website and there is no need to repeat ourselves. Most of the information can be taken right from their websites and is readily available. In your case, it is a good thing to specify that. If you need any help, I'm available to answer. If needed, you can move this discussion to a chat and continue there.

Comment: Another person recently voted this up. I plan to get back to it sometime.

Answer (score 10):

## Rebol 2

*Note: There is already [an answer for Rebol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44769/8845), but it is specific to Rebol 3, which has some significant differences. I wanted to highlight some of the features that are unique to Rebol 2 as these deserve a mention.*

***Factoid:*** Rebol stands for "Relative Expression Based Object Language". It is a [homoiconic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) language (that is, code and data are expressed the same way).

#### 1

```
?
```

This brings up the built-in help in the command-line interpreter. It is a [mezzanine function](http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-9.html#section-1).

#### 2

```
[]
```

Evaluates to an empty [block](http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-16.html#section-2.2) (type `block!`) which groups together values and functions and is a container for data until it is evaluated, in which case it is treated as code. Elements of blocks, even nested blocks, [can be accessed via a path](http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-7.html#section-2).

#### 3

```
pwd
```

Evaluates to a value of type `file!` that is the current working directory, just like in the shell! Rebol provides some familiar shell commands, like `cd`, `ls` `pwd` and `rm` as mezzanine functions which behave like they would in the shell, so you can navigate around, and work with the file-system and forget that you are actually in the Rebol interpreter!

#### 4

```
12x3
```

Pairs. They are everywhere, right? In spatial co-ordinates, screen dimensions, on the park bench. [`pair!`](http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-16.html#section-3.6) is another built-in type that consists of two integers separated by an `x`, just like you write it and would like to read it. But there's more: You can slice them, dice them, add and subtract them, get at their values with `/x` and `/y` (`/` being the refinement modifier that allows you to access things like values in objects or entries in arrays using a very natural, path-like syntax).

#### 5

```
2 + 2
```

The `+` here is in fact an operator function, or *infix* function, taking two arguments: one on the left and one on the right. Typing `? op!` at the Rebol console will give us a list of all these operators (type `op!`) which includes the usual suspects, like `!=` and `<>` (both meaning not equal), `**` (power-raiser) and `xor` (exclusive XOR) among others.

Answer (score 10):

## Axe Parser (Ti-83/84)

Axe is an extremely low level and loose syntax third party programming language for the ti83/84+ (z80) graphing calculators. Albeit its name, programs are compiled into z80 and not interpreted. Programs are usually written in the default ti-basic editor, so code is messured in tokens. Someting like "L6" or "End" take up only one byte, despite being more then one characters long.

[Site](http://axe.omnimaga.org/), [Doc/tutorial (outdated)](http://axe.eeems.ca/Documentation.pdf), and
[commands list](http://axe.eeems.ca/Commands.html) for my convince. I've not used the language since I got a laptop and learned Java. I'm not big into axe so please leave a comment for something cool or edit the answer if I've not touched it in a while.

**Factoid**
If your source isn't 'archived' or backed up, a crash will delete it along with the rest of the ram such as all your basic programs you actually use for class.

**Length 1:**

```
.
```

A comment. Placed on the first line of a program file it will cause an error in ti-basic. To the Axe compiler (a calculator 'application') and Axe aware shells, it means that the program (the only kind of file you can edit on the calculator) is an Axe source file. Characters that follow the `.` until a space are the name of the compiled program or application. After the space comes an optional description of the program that some shells will show. In the basic editor, the text of some basic tokens will now be changed to Axe commands if the 'help' option was enabled in the compiler application.

**Length 2:**

```
L6
```

A single token and Pointer to a 768 bytes block of memory that is "highly volatile". Drawing to the buffer will corrupt it. An experienced user will be able to use the L6 token to draw directly to the buffer, bypassing the drawing commands. It is *NOT* the ti-basic data token and has no relation to a basic list. When the programs ends it won't even be accessible like with basic variables. L1-5 also point to special free spaces of different sizes that are much more usable. Feel free to fill them up.

**Length 3:**

```
End
```

Ends a block of code. Unlike in Basic, every `If` needs an `End` because `Then` is not used.

**Length 4:**

```
→A→B
```

Store multiple values at once. `Ans` is implied. Could be `0→A→B`. This is actually optimized compared to `0→A:0→B`.  `0→A+2→B` also works and is optimized when 1 or 2 is added. The documentation provides many optimizations. In my experience they don't matter but I never pushed the calculator too much. I'm sure people have met the limits of the z80 though.

**Length 5:**

```
Lbl F
```

Defines label F. Labels are jumped to by `goto` and `sub(`. When the label is not a number, `F()` works like `sub(F)`.

**Length 6**

```
Return
```

"Returns from a subroutine. If not in a subroutine, the program will end." If a subroutine calls another subroutine on its tail, it does not need a return (though you may still want it for readability).

**Length 7**

```
Returnʳ
```

"Emergency exits the program from within any number of nested calls." The r is used to modify a lot of functions.

Comment: Is this the tokenized TI-basic, or another language?

Comment: @user23013, sorry I was a bit unclear. Axe is its own language that can use the tibasic editor. Basic tokens are redefined and the text of some are even changed

Answer (score 10):

## Tcl

See also [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44777/25180).

#### Factoid

In Tcl eval is not evil in most cases. And you can implement your own control structures using eval.

#### Length 1

```
h
```

If you run `tclsh` interactively, you need only to write the initial characters of a command, if it is not ambiguous. In this case, there is only one command `history` beginning with `h`. So it will print the command history, which is like this:

```
     1  h
```

If you try `a` instead, it will print something like this:

```
ambiguous command name "a": after append apply array auto_execok auto_import auto_load auto_load_index auto_qualify
```

#### Length 2

```
[]
```

It's the empty string, just like `""` and `{}`, but works differently. It executes the commands in the brackets, which are nothing, and substitute the result of the last command, which is empty.

The empty string is also a prefix of every command. So if you type `[]` directly in `tclsh`, you can get a list of all available commands while it complains that the empty string is ambiguous.

#### Length 3

```
end
```

Used in `lindex`, `lrange`, `string index`, `string range`, etc. While most languages require an extra operation to get the length of a string/list to specify a position at the end of the string, Tcl simply uses `end`. You can also use `end-k` where k is an integer, to make it more useful.

#### Length 4

```
"\{"
```

The string `{`. You can also use `"{"`, but that will cause you some trouble. The bodies of control structures in Tcl are parsed as strings, and the closing brace in the following code:

```
if 1 {puts "{"}
```

will match the opening brace in the `"{"`. So this code is an incomplete statement. You have to add another `}` to end the if statement.

You can escape the `{` to get rid of this problem. But of course, if your braces in the string are matched, you don't have to do anything. You can also make braces in different strings matched, which is still valid but may make the code less maintainable.

#### Length 5

```
{a b}
```

A list. Or just a whitespace-separated string. In case an element contains whitespaces or other special characters, they could be quoted using `{}` (which cannot contain unbalanced braces) or `""` (for whitespaces) or escaped using `\`. `""` and `\` can be combined together.

There are many commands working with lists. Basic ones are `list`, to generate a list from elements, and `lindex`, to get an element from a list.

#### Length 6

```
\{{}\}
```

Well, I can't think of a good one with length 6. So here is something random. Apparently Tcl checks only the first character in a word to decide whether it is the beginning of a `{}` quoted string. So you only have to escape the first `{` if it is not. Better also escape a matching `}` to make it matched for the reason described in the length 4 snippet.

#### Length 7

```
$a(a b)
```

Tcl also supports arrays, which are faster for random access than lists. The grammar for accessing an array is `$name(index)`. So there isn't such a thing as multidimensional array. What would you do if you need it to be multidimensional? Well, one way is to use a list as its index, as shown in this example. Note that the braces in `{a b}` are quotes of a string and not a part of the list itself, which are not used in the array access grammar. And make sure the list is in the canonical form generated using the `list` command if you do it this way.

It's not only for array indices. Variable names and even procedure names could also contain spaces or be empty.

After writing this I realized that it isn't as perfect as I thought. Normal variable names cannot both contain any `(` and end with a `)`. And array names cannot contain any `(`. It's also a bit more difficult to access a variable with `}` in its name, or an array with special characters in its name and also use lists as its index.

#### Length 8

```
if 0 [a]
```

`a` is executed before the if condition. If the condition is true, the result of `a` is parsed as commands and executed afterward. But `a` is always executed. I think I saw this used some times in the old underhanded or popcon questions.

Comment: 'eval is not evil' :) nice pun!

Answer (score 10):

## [Joe](https://github.com/JaniM/Joe)

#### Factoid

Joe is a language I've been working on for some time. It was designed to make list mappings and interactions with functions and other lists implicit and powerful.

#### Length 1

In Joe, the result of the last expression of every line that isn't a function, is printed. Thus, the following program prints `1` and exits. Note: the code is indented by 3, output by 0.

```
   1
1
```

#### Length 2

Functions can take one or two arguments. If called with one argument, the argument appears on the right side of the function. Monadic R gives range from 0 to y, excluding.

```
   R5
0 1 2 3 4
```

#### Length 3

If a function is called with two arguments, they surround the function. Here we call R with arguments 2 and 7. Dyadic R gives range from x to y, inclusive.

```
   2R7
2 3 4 5 6 7
   7R2
7 6 5 4 3 2
```

#### Length 4

Joe does have higher-order functions,  but they cannot be defined by the user. Not that you would want to.

```
:/>c
```

Here, `>c` ("greater choose") is a function that returns the greater one of it's parameters  (`1>c4` returns 4). `/` takes it and returns a function that applies the `>c` between the items of it's arguments (think of rfold1). So, `/>c` is a max function! `:` then saves it to name F. Let's test this out.

```
   F1 2 3
3
   F1 3 2
3
```

#### Length 5

Joe has some handy ways to control data flow. Let's see one of them.

```
   O$rMH"Shelly""Leo""Mike"
Leo
Mike
Shelly

   O$rME"Shelly""Leo""Mike"
Mike
Leo
Shelly
```

Here you see two versions of a simple sorting function `O$rM<rule>`. The rule can basically be replaced by any function you want to. I'll use the `H`-rule (head) in the following explanation, which shows the steps taken to achieve this result.

To get the first letters from the strings for the sorting, we map head to them.

```
   MH"Shelly""Leo""Mike"
SLM
```

We then want to pass this as the left parameter to the sorting function `O` and the original list as the right parameter. We can do this using tacit composition (you can find more on the matter in Joe's quick reference).

```
   {MHOA)"Shelly""Leo""Mike"
Leo
Mike
Shelly
```

Because this is so common pattern, I've created a shorthand `$r` for it. `O$rMH` is equal to `{MHOA)`.

#### Length 6

Function composition is vital in Joe. It is the only way to create any kind of data flow. See, for example, a factorial function.

```
/*-l1R
```

How does it work? The arguments are always passed to the rightmost function, from where they're cascaded back in the chain. `1R` gives a list from 1 to the argument (inclusive). `-l` removes all zeroes ("minus list"). This allows the function to work correctly when passed a zero. Lastly, `/*` multiplies all values together to create the result. Now, at this point the implicit looping capabilities of Joe start to pop in. Observe.

```
   F:/*-l1R
   F5
120
   FR10
1 1 2 6 24 120 720 5040 40320 362880
```

Note: the function definition could be inlined and left unassigned.

**Edit**: Joe received backwards uncompatible update. All examples updated.

Answer (score 10):

## [Clip](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Clip)

## Factoid

The empty program in Clip copies its input to the output (i.e. the cat program). This is because an incomplete expression takes the missing part as a string from stdin. Here, the whole thing is missing, so that is used. Each program just prints the result of an expression, here a simple string.

## Length 1 snippet

```
A
```

I've seen obsolete features, but this... `A` is a supplier which returns the alphabet in upper case. This therefore outputs it.

## Length 2 snippet

```
1A
```

If you have more than one expression at the root, only the first is evaluated and printed. Therefore, this program prints `1`.

## Length 3 snippet

```
\{`
```

Lists use the syntax `{elem1elem2..elemn<backtick>` (can't actually put a backtick there for formatting issues). There is no separator, as Clip can figure out how many expressions there are. The reason for this weird syntax is that `{` initialises a ListBuilder, which consumes all expressions it receives and shoves them on its list. Backticks escape things, for example `+<backtick>` is the plus function in a format that can pass it to other functions. However, ListBuilders happen to become a list when escaped, so that's what happens.

Finally, the `\` function converts a list to a human-readable string i.e. `{1 2 3 4 5<backtick>` becomes `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` instead of the default `12345`. The output of my length 3 snippet is not `{}`, however, as the default formatting for empty lists is as strings (lists of numbers with ischar: true). It is therefore `""`.

## Length 4 snippet

```
bW42
```

`W` is a supplier that always returns 2 (this allows for no spaces between 2 and 42 here; just `242` would be interpreted as the number 242). `bxy` *supposedly* converts `y` to base `x` and returns a list of digits. So, what *should* this snippet return? `101010`, for 42 in base 2. But it actually returns `21010`. I don't know why, but that is not base 2. If you replace the 2 with 10, however, this function will always give the right answer (because in base *x*, 10 = *x*).

Edit: Turns out this was a bug in the v2 interpreter I was using; v5 seems to handle it correctly and print `101010`.

## Length 5 snippet

```
"..."
```

You expect this to print `...` (though the second quote would be unneeded), but `.` is Clip's escape character - like most languages' `\`. If you imagine this as `"\\\"`, it becomes clearer that the first escape escapes the second to make a literal `.`, and the last escape escapes the second quote to make it literally `"`. There is no closing quote, as these are unneeded, so this snippet prints `."`.

Answer (score 10):

## **[The Hexadecimal Stacking Pseudo-Assembly Language](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Hexadecimal_Stacking_Pseudo-Assembly_Language)**

Alright, this is one of the several languages I've designed myself, and one of the only <s>two</s> three that has been implemented thus far. The program is represented as a list of 6-digit base-16 unsigned integers. Line breaks between them are optional, but not required. All other whitespace is forbidden.

It is intended to resemble  a form of bytecode, even though, in reality, it isn't one. Its lack of readability may well make it a Turing Tarpit, despite the fact that it has more features than most Turing Tarpits.

Edit: It has been suggested that I score each hexit/nybble as half a byte. I think this is reasonable, so I'll go with it.

Therefore:

**Length 1 snippet:** `11`

A command that takes a number from input. Another four hexits are required to make it syntactically valid, the next two provide a stack address and the last two are ignored.

**Length 3 snippet:** `110000`

Takes a number from the input and pushes it to stack `00`, the last two hexits are ignored but are required for the command to be syntactically valid.

**Length 6 snippet:** `400000400100`

Pushes a zero to stack `00`, and then another zero to `01`. When using the first two stacks as a tape (and the third for scratch work) this is how you would initialize it at the beginning of the program, pushing a zero to stack `00`, then another zero to stack `01`.

**Length 9 snippet:** `200001400000210000`

In the Brainf*** equivalence described in the documentation, this is the substitution given for the `+` instruction. It creates the constant 1, pushes it to stack `00`, then pops the top two values of stack `00` and pushes their sum.

`+`, `.`, and `,` have the three shortest substitutions given.

Comment: Not sure if this applies, but if we're going by entropy, we would score a length-6 hex entry as 3 bytes as in http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/546/fair-size-comparison-across-languages-with-different-source-alphabets

Comment: So... should we do that for this?

Comment: It's your choice I think; the brainfuck answer scores by characters but since this is literally hex you could score by entropy.

Answer (score 10):

### [ChucK](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/)

**Factoid**

ChucK is a time-based programming language that handles sound synthesis. It has most standard functions, as well as multiple sound generators and ways to modify waveforms.

**Length 2 snippet**

```
=>
```

This is the ChucK symbol. It requires a "chucker" to the right of the symbol and a "chuckee" to the left. What it does depends on the syntax: If it's given an integer as the chucker and a initialized integer variable as the chuckee, it will store the integer in the variable. If it's given a sound unit as the chucker and a modifier/output as the chuckee, it will send the sound through the modifier/output.

**Length 3 snippet**

```
dur
```

When initializing a variable, you can make the variable type a duration by using this command. In doing so, durations in time can be stored in the variable (useful for allowing sounds to end before moving on in code).

**Length 5 snippet**

```
5::ms
```

This is another snippet to do with time. `ms` means milliseconds, and the 5 is literal. This is the format for a duration in ChucK, and can be assigned to a dur variable.

Answer (score 10):

## Casio-BASIC

Casio BASIC is very unlike TI-BASIC; firstly, it doesn't require as much RAM, memory or power. Programs typically only use a few KB of RAM. Secondly, it allows scrolling through the list of functions to write a program, or the use of special buttons which insert common characters. However, unlike TI-BASIC, functions can simply be typed in letter by letter from the keyboard.

### Length 8 snippet

```
Print 9!
```

This prints 9 factorial, which is 362880.

### Length 9 snippet

```
Print n+n
```

Even though we didn't define `n`, the calculator doesn't throw an error. Instead, it treats `n` as an expression, and prints out `2·n`. (A floating dot is used by the calculator to represent multiplication)

### Length 13 snippet

```
DrawGraph x^2
```

Opens an empty graph plane, and draws the graph of y=x^2 onto it.

### Length 15 snippet

```
seq(x^2,x,1,10)
```

This will print `x^2` for all values of `x` between 1 and 10.

Comment: Is it suited for golfing?

Comment: It probably isn't.

Comment: Add some snipits?

Answer (score 10):

## [Beam](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beam)

#### Factoid

Beam is a 2-dimensional language designed in 2010 by an Esolangs Wiki user named [Feuermonster](http://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Feuermonster), and was originally implemented in 2012. It was re-discovered by me while looking for an interesting language with which to answer the famous ["Hello, World!" catalog](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422/42545). The official interpreter has been lost, but PPCG user [MickyT](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31347/mickyt) has developed a [Stack Snippet interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57190/42545).

Beam is based off of three storage values:

- the beam, the primary storage; holds one unsigned 8-bit integer.
- the store, the secondary storage; holds one unsigned 32-bit integer.
- the memory, a (theoretically) infinite tape of unsigned 8-bit integers.

#### Length 1 snippet

```
H
```

Yay, our first full program! Unfortunately, we can hardly do anything in just 1 byte. `H` simply halts execution of the program, so from this, we get no output at all.

#### Length 2 snippet

```
:H
```

Now we get a chance to see some output. `:` prints the value of the beam as a number, so this program outputs `0`. If we were to drop the `H`, it would still print `0`, but it would also give us the error message `Beam is lost in space`. This error occurs anytime the beam travels beyond the bounds of the program.

#### Length 3 snippet

```
r@H
```

First lessons in inputting: `r` sets the beam to the char code of the next character in STDIN. `@` is like `:`, except that it outputs as a character instead of a number. All in all, this program outputs the next character from the input. Not that useful, but pretty decent for 3 bytes. ;)

#### Length 4 snippet

```
++:H
```

Here we have the new character `+`. Can you guess what it does? (Hint: this program outputs the number `2`.)

#### Length 5 snippet

```
v
\:H
```

Finally, a chance to use Beam's 2D instruction plane! Beam has four arrows `^v<>`, which set the direction of the beam, and four mirrors `\/|_`, which reflect the beam in another direction. It also has several conditional direction changers, which we'll get into in a little bit.

#### Length 6 snippet

```
)n+!
 H
```

Here we demonstrate a few of the conditional statements. `)` and `(` change direction to left or right if the store <> 0. `!` and `?` reverse the flow direction depending of the value of the beam.  `n` and `u` change the flow direction to up or down if the beam != the store.
So in the snippet above, `)` does not change the direction since the store is 0, the flow continues through `n` as the beam and store are both 0.  `+` increments the beam. `!` reverses the flow since the beam is now 1. `+` the beam again.  `n` now changes the flow direction down since the beam is 2 while the store is still 0.  `H`alt the program.

#### Length 7 snippet

```
+P+:p:H
```

Bit of a boring snippet, but it demonstrates the setting and retrieving of memory values.  `P` will set the memory at store position to the beam value.  `p` will set the beam to the value at the stores memory position.  In this example the beam is incremented to one.  Memory location 0(store) is set to 1(beam). The beam is incremented and the value printed.  Memory location 0 is retrieved into the beam and printed.  The output is `21`

More to come as this answer recieves more votes!

Comment: :D awesome. Yeah, I cleaned-up my vServer a while ago and most of the eso stuff got lost :(. Thanks for keeping it alive.

Comment: @mroman  Thanks for a fun little language to play with.  I hope the snippet does what it should.

Comment: I wrote an interpreter in python for it today: https://gist.github.com/FMNSSun/3cc9c08e69a98eb0ae01 I hope I didn't make any mistakes.

Answer (score 10):

## [Math++](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Math%2B%2B)

The latest addition to my arsenal of custom languages. Also the first to include a mathematical expression parser. Operates exclusively on 64-bit IEEE754 floats.

Control flow consists exclusively of evaluated gotoes.

**Length 1 snippet:** `?`

A special expression that returns a number taken from the input.

**Length 2 snippet:** `!0`

Returns `NOT 0`, which obviously equals `1`.

(If you call the `!` operator on any value other than `0`, it returns `0`)

**Length 3 snippet:** `0>$`

This is the first snippet here to show the `>` symbol, which, in this language, is not a greater than operator but rather a symbol to separate an expression from its (optional) target designator. (The target designator `out`, meaning that the result should be printed to the output, is the default.) In this case, the target designator `$` indicates that the result should be floored and then stored to the instruction pointer (thereby going to that number line.) Going to line `0` is considered an exit statement, going to any other out-of-bounds line number triggers an exception.

**Length 4 snippet:** `_a>a`

Floors the value stored in `a`, then stores the result back to `a`.

**Length 5 snippet:** `1>{0}`

Associates the value `1` to the key `0` in the map.

**Length 6 snippet:** `cbrt$e`

An expression that yields [image]

(`$e` is Euler's constant, just plain `e` is a variable; the language also supports pi (`$pi`) and the golden ratio (`$phi`))

**Length 7 snippet:** `9*$rand`

`$rand` returns a random floating-point value greater than or equal to 0 but less then 1. Therefore, this expression returns a random floating-point value greater than or equal to 0 but less then 9.

**Length 8 snippet:** `sin$pi|1`

We've got logical operators, too!

This *should* return 1, but because of a rounding error in the evaluation of `sin$pi`, it yields 1.2246467991473532E-16. Darn you, IEEE.

Answer (score 10):

## [EGSHEL (the Extensible Golfing Scripting High Efficiency Language) v0.1](https://catb0t.github.io/egshel)

Currently in development, EGSHEL is a highly extensible turing-complete object-oriented stack-aware scripting language intended mostly for golfing but which, especially due to a Pythonic module-importing structure, is designed to be useful in other ways, as a general purpose language. It's influenced by Pyth, <s>LOLCODE,</s> GolfScript, Python, BrainFuck, and more.

 Incidentally, its error-allowing parser and ignorance of unused or explicitly undefined characters make it very useful for polyglots with other, "real" languages like C, Python and Javascript.
**Factoid:** <s>LOLScript</s> EGSHEL has two basic parser modes: Concise, which binds builtins to lowercase letters and makes everything tiny, and Verbose, the default, which can can parse Concise code but, as the name suggests, is less tiny and more readable.
The name EGSHEL is both a [backronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backronym) and intended to convey that due to implicit, inferential types and other such features.
<s>Originally designated LOL<s>Golf</s> LOLScript, <s>it's clear from where LOLScript gets its name (which will probably change soon): LOLCODE.</s> I was trying to make a meaningful program for Mystery String Printer in less than 128 bytes but LC has more than that in boilerplate just to make a loop. 

(In practice, however, LS does not look or work at all remotely like LC. The first spec isn't even done but all we've copied from LC into LS so far is "vsb" to print strings (from LC's VISIBLE builtin.))</s>

### 1 Char:

```
;
```

A semicolon is not so interesting but extremely useful. It can turn lines that would otherwise need to end in a newline, into a continuous line, and when found after a statement within either the first or last 3 lines of the file, sets some interesting mode-related options.
On its own line, though, it denotes the respective beginning or end of a readable file and if only one is found near either the top or bottom of the file, it gives execute precedence to that "side" of the file. 
Execute precedence is something more easily explained with more chars but basically, it sets the initial reading direction: up or down the file.

 In Concise mode, since Concise programs are almost always one line, an otherwise unecessary leading or trailing semicolon denotes the left/right reading direction on a per-character basis. But, I need more votes to explain further.

### 2 Chars:

```
-|
```

A hyphen directly followed by a vertical bar is, at least for now, a single line comment initiator in Verbose mode. 
 In Concise mode, unless the Concise code is embedded within a Verbose function or block, there are no comments and this denotes <s>something</s> nothing, yet. 

If a `-|` is found more two or more spaces after a valid grouping of characters on a line in a Concise block in an otherwise Verbose script, it is a single line comment.

### 3 Chars:

```
1~B
```

Finally something unique! Take a guess as to what this does...
If you guessed that it results in the second last (zero-indexed) history index of  B, then you would be right!
History indicies allow direct access to a given variable's given 0 (represented by a solo tilde preceding a var) - Fh-th previous value. 
What, you may ask, is the point? Well, as an example, when you use a similar statement `~1B`, the result is the two (0 & 1) previous variables and B's current value concatenated based on their types. EGSHEL is dynamically typed and object-oriented thus it's up to the programmer to explicitly cast otherwise implicit types when needed. ~*B results in all previous values of B concatenated, incidentally.

### 4 Chars

```
#0(y
```

Calls the first defined anonymous function in a file with y as an argument. functions are defined like `$foo(args{body}` but if you leave out the function name *foo*, it becomes anonymous, is put into a numbered list, and you must call it as above. normal functions are called with their name as expected: `foo(args`.

### 5 Chars:

```
{:x:y}
```

Simple for loop, for *i* (that's i for Implied Imaginary) in x do y. More colons can expand  this into a first, second, third C-style loop.

Comment: Note that when I say this language is "currently in development," I mean *I just started writing the spec for v0.1 yesterday and I'm less than a quarter done.* I wonder how long it will be before we've got an interpreter or I can use LS on PPCG...

Comment: I really want to write a program in this now. :( Too bad there's no interpreter

Comment: @ev3commander oh, dear... I had abandoned this project... if you're interested (in helping?), I'll finish the [spec](https://github.com/catb0t/egshel) and prototype *something* (because I currently have no idea how to write an interpreter, and I'm also working on [mouse15](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse15))

Comment: @ev3commander the syntax in its current form is gonna be a *pain* to parse, so I need to work on that.

Answer (score 10):

## PoGo

#### Factoid

[PoGo](http://esolangs.org/wiki/PoGo) is an esoteric programming language that consists only of two letter commands with one vowel and one consonant each, designed to make the source code read funny. It operates on a two dimensional memory grid and three different stacks.

#### 2 Characters

```
qi
```

Output:

```
poqigo
```

`qi` is one of the special purpose output commands, just for fun (others include `wo` wich outputs "Hello, world!"). What's special about `poqigo`? Wait for the 6 characters program!

#### 4 Characers

```
isis
```

Output (example):

```
What is my purpose?
What is my purpose?
```

`is` is another special purpose output command, specified as "have an existentialist crisis". The message is choosen randomly, but at least in the official implementation it is memoized so that calling `is` twice gives the same output twice.

#### 6 Characters

```
poqigo
```

Output:

```
poqigopoqigopoqigopoqigopoqigopoqigopoqigopoqigopoqigopoqigopoqigopoqigopoqigopoqigo[...]
```

In the documentation, `poqigo` is mentioned as an example for a quine and obviously that's the only purpose of the `qi` command, but it actually isn't a real quine since it outputs itself infinitely, not just once.

With this example we learn the basics of flow control in PoGo. You use a call stack (the "po" stack):

- `po` - add current position in code to the top of the po stack
- `go` - pop the most recent po location off the stack and jump there

So `po` ... `go` produces a loop and if you don't use any conditions to break out of it, it's an endless loop

Comment: Six votes. What on _earth_ is `poqigo`? :)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ There you go :)

Answer (score 10):

## [Thue](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Thue)

Thue (the correct pronounciation is either "TOO-eh" or "TOO-ay", I've heard both) is a language based on nondeterministic string rewriting. It is presumably named after Norwegian mathematitcian Axel Thue. A program consists of a list of zero or more substitution rules (terminated by the null rule), followed by a string indicating the initial state.

**Length 1:** `~`

Prepending a tilde to the right side of a rule is the language's only way to produce output. Basically, when that rule is applied, the target substring, instead of being replaced with the string on the right side of the rule, is removed and the remainder of the string (everything after the `~`) on the right side of the rule is printed to the output. (A rule may be applied to any substring of the state which matches the rule's left side.)

When used in this way, a tilde is often read as "print".

**Length 3:** `::=`

These three characters (typically read as "can mean") are used to separate the left side of a rule from the right side.

When both sides of a rule are empty, it serves as the null rule, which terminates the rule list (what should happen when only the left side is empty is undefined, most implementations treat it as equivalent to both sides being empty. It is, however, perfectly valid for only the right side to be empty.)

**Length 4:** `0::=`

This is a complete rule dictating that instances of the substring "0" may be removed and discarded.

**Length 5:** `0::=0`

This is a complete rule dictating that instances of the substring "0" may be replaced with... itself. This can be used to construct a simple infinite loop, as seen [here.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59347/shortest-infinite-loop-producing-no-output/63812#63812)

**Length 6:** `ab::=~`

This is a complete rule dictating that instances of the substring "ab" may be removed, printing the empty string. As the specs don't actually provide any way of printing a newline, some implementations will do this when the empty string is printed.

**Length 7:** `a::=:::`

When three colons are used as the right side of a rule, this means the replacement string should be taken from STDIN. Thus, this rule dictates that instances of the substring "a" can be replaced with strings from STDIN.

Triple colons used in this way are read as "input".

Answer (score 10):

### Length 10 Snippet

```
ɟ⍞#rœэ¡²Ĩċ
```

Here's a really nasty infinite loop. It uses jQuery to press the "Run" button, which will execute the code that presses the "Run" button, which will execute... You get the idea. Even worse, it's impossible to stop without force-quitting Firefox itself, so be careful when running.

Also, this snippet uses compression: `э¡²Ĩċ` decompresses to `\`click`.

### Length 9 Snippet

```
ᵭꞒ↷+⬭+ᶑꞒ㘯
```

This is a fancy way of outputting `Hello world`. It uses the builtin Scrabble dictionary.

### Length 8 Snippet

```
ʗć⁽ḊḞĒ`X
```

This outputs `X` to the canvas. Yes,  has a canvas.

### Length 7 Snippet

```
ⓑᴙą1
```

Determines how even `ï` is. Notice that the `ï` at the end is missing (which is allowed through implicit input behavior).

### Length 6 Snippet

```
⟮ɕṡ+ᶈ0
```

This is a quine. `⟮` (copy block) stores any code after it into an array, `ɕṡ` is the `⟮` character, and `ᶈ0` gets the stored code.

### Length 5 Snippet

```
ɟ⍘*Ĭ)
```

This removes all of the interpreter's HTML using jQuery. It's an example of how manipulative  can get with the interpreter's code.

### Length 4 Snippet

```
¡МĂï
```

This calculates the factorial of `ï`. One difference: this uses a bignumber function to calculate values greater than 171 (JS's ordinary limit) accurately and quickly.

### Length 3 Snippet

```
Мȫï
```

This outputs the `ï`th Fibonacci number. `Мȫ` is a math lib builtin.

### Length 2 Snippet

```
⩤Ṥ
```

This outputs from 0 to 100. `⩤` is the inclusive range function, and `Ṥ` is the alias for 100. There are variables for numbers from 0 to 256.

### Length 1 Snippet

```
ï
```

Here's a `cat` program! Quite simply, it gets user input and *implicitly* outputs it. Note that a 0-byte program would also be a `cat` program because of implicit input behavior.

### Factoid

(or ESMin for any of y'all who can't see the doublestruck chars) is a code-golfing language (sort of) based on Javascript ES6. Its code page contains almost 1024 chars to account for the various aliases present.

Comment: I just discovered that your title actually renders properly in firefox (it doesn't here in chrome)

Comment: For me, it renders fine on my Mac and in ChromeOS, but not in Windows 7.

Comment: I really should learn this.

Comment: I'm currently working on updating the docs... Perhaps you should look at the source code of the interpreter for now (if you are familiar with Javascript ES6).

Comment: @SuperJedi224 For the first time ever, I can see the title in all browsers!

Answer (score 10):

## LabVIEW

LabVIEW is a graphical programming language mainly used for measurement technology.

#### Factoid:

LabVIEW used to store Bools in 2 Bytes

Note: since LabVIEW is strictly graphical the sizes are in [Labview Primitives](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7589/39490)

#### Lenght 1 Snippet

[image]

LabVIEW is used in 2 windows, the left one (Block Diagramm) where the programming happens and the right one (Front Panel) for in and output. Putting a control on the Block Diagramm automatically puts the input on the Front Panel

#### Lenght 2 Snippet

there is actually no working programm of size 2 apart from just putting 2 controls or constants, so ill add another fact.

LabVIEW works exceptionally well with Arrays. They can be automatically indexed when put into a for loop and you can easily use basic arithmetic and binary operations on arrays and numerics of different dimensions.

#### Lenght 3 Snippet

[image]

I just realized i could use express VIs but that feels like cheating. They are basically full written out programms that get compressed into 1 VI.
I might put one in if anyone wants to see it, so leave a comment.

#### Lenght 5 Snippet

[image]

This is one of the array operations one can do.

#### Lenght 6 Snippet

Another fact:

The size of a full LabVIEW installation can be well over 20 GB.

Answer (score 10):

## [Mouse-2002](https://github.com/catb0t/newmouse/blob/master/mouse.c)

---

#### Length 6

```
&GMSUN
```

Pushes on the stack `1.32712438E+20` (in scientific notation!), or the gravitational mass of the sun.<sup>[2](http://mouse.davidgsimpson.com/mouse2002/ref2002.html)</sup>

#### Length 5

```
&SWAP
```

Swaps the top two things on the stack. Concisely, `( x y -- y x )`. Again, not that interesting; most mouse programs have to be somewhat longer to be interesting.

#### Length 4

```
&DUP
```

Duplicates the thing on the top of the stack. That is, makes a copy, and pushes that copy. Unfortunately expensive in terms of bytes. I think it was not the first thing on Simpson's list of easy-to-access functions.

Not particularly interesting.

If you've ever seen or written False (or, for that matter, False!) or, indeed, Forth, you'll notice a lot of Mouse is shockingly similar. I love Forth, and my guess is False's creator had perhaps heard of Mouse (because Mouse far predates False, but is predated by Forth by 9 years).

#### Length 3

```
&AU
```

Pushes "the value of one astronomical unit of distance"<sup>[1](http://mouse.davidgsimpson.com/mouse2002/ref2002.html)</sup> to the stack. The guy who reimplemented and updated this language had a hand on programming spaceships at NASA for the Apollo missions, so it figures he'd include a whole bunch of physics and maths related constants.

My reboot of the language will also contain these constants, because they're cool.

#### Length 2

```
A:
```

Takes the thing on the top of the stack and puts it in `A`. e.g, `1A:` puts 1 into A, and `3 5/A:` puts 3/5 into A. (oh yeah, Mouse uses Reverse-Polish-Notation!)

#### Length 1

```
?
```

Prompts for a *number* to be input, and puts it on the stack.

#### Factoid:

Mouse-2002 is an updated [reimplementation](http://mouse.davidgsimpson.com/mouse2002/index.html) of Mouse-83 by David Simpson. Mouse-83 was described in the book *Mouse: A Language for Microcomputers* by Peter Grogono. It includes a number of enhancements over the earlier version, Mouse-79, which was described in an article by Grogono in Byte magazine in July 1979.

Mouse is a rather ancient, yet turing-complete stack based language, which, while no instruction uses more than a byte, is still likely less golfy than CJam or Pyth.

Fixed interpreter [here](https://github.com/catb0t/newmouse/blob/master/mouse.c).

I'm planning to update it and reboot it with even more concise syntax and better features; no interpreter yet, though. It will be almost as golfy as CJam (though that isn't the main intent) while being far more readable and usable outside codegolf.

Answer (score 10):

## MIPS

**Factoid:** Though many see MIPS's heyday is in the past with ARM taking over the market, the classic RISC design often taught in universities continues to be widely used in embedded devices and newer small devices in Asian markets.

**Length 1**

Being assembly, not much can be done in one instruction. That being said, MIPS does offer an interesting native (not psuedo-) instruction: BGEZAL, *Branch on greater than or equal to zero and link*.

```
Hex code      Syntax
0x05110000    bgezal $t0, label
```

Answer (score 10):

## [Cy](https://github.com/cyoce/Cy)

Cy is a postfix language that operates on a stack. Cy is meant to be somewhat-practical, meaning I do things like use actual words and have insignificant white space, in sharp contrast with my previous languages.

---

*If I explain things poorly or you want to try it yourself, feel free to install the [Ruby interpreter](https://github.com/cyoce/Cy)*

---

I will be using the following format in examples (this is the format used by the Ruby interpreter's REPL (accessible via the `-r` parameter (ooh nested parentheticals! I should try lisp next!))):

```ruby
>>> 
:: [initial stack]

>>> some code
:: [resulting stack]

>>> some more code
:: [resulting stack]
```

---

### Factoid

The order  in which operands are expected on the stack is based not on what makes sense, but the order in which it would be most convenient to pass on arguments in a [tacit style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming), i.e. taking arguments in the same order as they would most likely be passed to a user-defined function. More on this later.

### Length 1 Snippet

```ruby
1
```

This pushes the number `1` to the stack.

Example:

```ruby
>>>    
:: []

>>> 1
:: [1]
```

### Length 2 Snippet

```ruby
$x
```

This pushes the value stored in the variable `x` to the stack. Assigning values to variables is covered below.

### Length 3 Snippet

```ruby
"a"
```

This pushes the string `"a"` to the stack. Pretty self-explanatory. Note that single quotes `'` cannot be used for this purpose.

Example:

```ruby
>>> "a" # string 
:: ["a"]

>>> 'a' # error
Error
  @ `'a'`
```

### Length 4 Snippet

```ruby
tran
```

`tran` is an incredibly useful built-in I just implemented. This operator is used to define a stack `tran`sformation. It takes two arrays describing the old and new state of the stack. The second array should be a shuffled version of the first, and the stack will be modified accordingly.

Example:

```ruby
>>>
:: [1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> [.a, .b] [.b, .a] tran
:: [1, 2, 4, 3]

>>> [1, 2] [2, 1, 2] tran
:: [1, 2, 3, 4, 3]
```

### Length 5 Snippet

```ruby
10 =x
```

This is the syntax for setting variable `x`. Note that the `=` sign has to be *touching* the identifier; `10 = x` would do something different.

### Length 6 Snippet

```ruby
&print
```

Now we get into the interesting stuff. `print` is a function that pops something from the stack and outputs it. `&` is a prefix that makes its function peek from the stack instead of popping it. This means that the top of the stack will be outputted, but still left on the stack.

### Length 7 Snippet

```ruby
{10} if
```

This showcases two things - blocks and if-statements. A block holds a piece of code. The block `{10}` is a block that pushes `10` to the stack. The `if` command pops a value from the stack, and if it is truthy, executes the given block. In this case, it would push `10` to the stack.

Example

```ruby
>>>
:: [0]

>>> {10} if
:: []
```

```ruby
>>>
:: [1]

>>> {10} if
:: [10]
```

## Length 8 Snippet

```ruby
{3 2 ^-}
```

This demonstrates another modifier, related to `&`. Without the `^`, the block `{3 2 -}` would just push the difference of 3 and 2 (1). However, the `^` in front of `-` makes it do something special. If the block is called with an `&`, it will execute `&-` (peek for operands); if not, it will execute `-` (pop the operands).

Example

```ruby
>>> {3 2 ^-} =f
:: []

>>> f
:: [1]

>>> &f
:: [1, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: 5 votes--how to assign a variable? :3

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ read on and find out!

Comment: What would `0=x` do?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ that would push `0` to the stack, but that's just a quirk of Ruby number parsing.

Answer (score 10):

## [eacal](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/eacal)

### 0-vote

eacal is a language made by me in 2016. It's very extremely verbose, but, as I hope, is capable. There is one command per line, and each data entry is separated by spaces. It is meant to be classified under a lot of programming paradigms, which includes right now, imperative, structured, stack-based, object oriented, event-driven, and a tad of functional.

Fun fact: the empty program errors.

### 1-vote

```
v
```

This prints:

```
eacal is currently running.
```

This tells you if eacal is still alive. Helpful!

### 2-vote

```
on
```

This is the event-driven portion of eacal. It's syntax is:

```
on <event> <code evaluating to a function>
```

Here is an example:

```
on end eval print string Done!

print string Running...
```

This prints:

```
Running...
Done!
```

### 3-vote

```
arg
```

This returns all of the command-line arguments passed to the program. Like so:

```
node eacal.js <file> 3 4 Hello
```

File:

```
print arg
```

Output:

```
[ '3', '4', 'Hello' ]
```

### 4-vote

```
init
```

This is used to initialize stacks, like so:

```
init main
```

Otherwise, the stack does not exist.

### 5-vote

```
alias
```

This sets creates a command that function the same as another command. Example:

```
alias define_stack init
define_stack main
```

is the same as

```
init main
```

This is very helpful in golfing.

### 6-vote

```
string
```

Represents a string, where it's arguments are joined by spaces. So, `Hello, World!` is this:

```
string Hello, World!
```

### 7-vote

```
numlist
```

This returns an array of numbers representative of its arguments. For the first few Fibonacci numbers in a list:

```
numlist 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21
```

### 8-vote

```
func add
```

This shows some of eacal's function programming. You can execute it on a stack named `k` using `exec k--func add`. For example:

```
init main
push main number 5
push main number 8
print exec main--func add
; outputs 13
```

Answer (score 10):

### [Oasis](http://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis)

#### Factoid

Oasis is a language made by Adnan specialized in number sequences.

You can try it online [here](http://oasis.tryitonline.net/).

#### Length 1

```
n
```

Not very interesting, just push `n` (The current argument) and print it because implicit output.

#### Length 2

```
n1
```

Same as the previous snippet, but give `1` for the argument `0`.

Oasis programs can have a list of hardcoded definitions for special cases.

So `n1` can be described in pseudocode as:

```
A(n) = n
A(0) = 1
```

Special cases and indexes are reversed, so to make

```
A(0) = 1
A(1) = 4
```

The correct special cases definition is `41`

As @Adnan pointed it out, another interesting snippet is the fibonnaci sequence:

```
+T
```

Because `T` is replaced with `10`, so this is expanded to

```
+10
```

Which mean

```
A(n) = A(n - 1) + A(n - 2)
A(0) = 0
A(1) = 1
```

#### Length 3

```
n*1
```

Finally, an useful snippet!

This calculate a factorial.

```
     A(n) = n * A(n - 1)
n    Push n
 *   Multiply two items on the stack
     Because there is only one item on the stack, A(n-1) is pushed
  1  A(0) = 1
```

#### Length 4

```
n*x1
```

Showcase the command `x` (Double a number).

This is basically a factorial, but double the number returned by `n*A(n-1)`.

```
A(n) = n * A(n - 1) * 2
A(0) = 1
```

#### Length 5

```
Tnm>1
```

Calculate [A000533](https://oeis.org/A000533)

```
       A(n) = 10^n + 1
T      Push 10
 n     Push n
  m    Power
   >   Increment
    1  A(0) = 1
```

#### Length 6

```
Tnm<9÷
```

[A002275](https://oeis.org/A002275) aka repunits

```
        A(n) = (10^n - 1) / 9
T       Push 10
 n      Push n
  m     Power
   <    Decrement
    9   Push 9
     ÷  Floor divide
```

Comment: Another interesting 2 byte submission is `+T`, which is the Fibonacci sequence :).

Comment: You can also add a Length 6 snippet.

Answer (score 10):

> <s>Author's note: While more snippets have been prepared, I will honor the original restriction somewhat and wait for interest.</s>
>   **EDIT**: It's been months,
>   and I suddenly realized I have a bunch of examples I haven't posted.
>   I'd hate for them to go unshared, so here they are now.
>   (new examples start at 16 bytes)

## Zsh

Zsh may seem like a new language, given the (relatively) recent popularity of the "Oh My Zsh" framework,
but it in fact dates back to 1990, just one year after Bash released.
Zsh's syntax is inspired by the bourne shell and ksh.

Many people are familiar with Bash scripting, but don't understand how Zsh differs. Zsh brings a surprising amount of powerful constructs.
I'll be highlighting these differences here.

### Length 1 Snippet

```sh
:
```

This is equivalent to the command `true`. It returns zero (truthy in shell scripts).
Uses for this include short bodyless `for` loops: `for ((x;y;z)):`

### Length 2 Snippet

```sh
$a
```

Parameter expansion. If `a` is set to some value, substitute that value.

Unlike in Bash and POSIX shells, if `$a` is an array, this will expand to all *non-empty* elements
(or, in the language of shells, "words") of `$a`.

### Length 3 Snippet

```sh
$=s
```

This is equivalent to the expansion `${=s}`, which induces word splitting.
For parameter expansion forms that involve a prefix (except for flags, see below) or modifiers (see below)
the surrounding braces can be removed if unambiguous.

Unlike in Bash and POSIX shells, word splitting is *not* done on parameters by default.
To split on `$IFS`, this construct is needed, or the option `shwordsplit` needs to be set.

### Length 4 Snippet

```sh
*(.)
```

When expanding globs, Zsh supports *glob qualifiers* specified in parentheses after the glob.
Appending `(.)` as above will cause this glob to expand to all regular files in the directory.
There are dozens of globbing qualifiers, here are just a few:

- `/`: Directories
- `F`: Non-empty directories
- `@`: Symlinks
- `U`: Files owned by the effective UID
- `Yn`: When `n` is a number, expand to the first `n` matches.

### Length 5 Snippet

```sh
${~x}
```

This will expand `x` as a *glob*.
This is useful to match filenames, match `case` expressions, and in `[[` tests.

### Length 6 Snippet

```sh
${s:l}
```

Zsh supports various *modifiers* to parameter expansion.
The `l` modifier will lowercase all words of `s`.
The equivalent construct in bash is `"${s,,}"` (or if `s` is an array: `"${s[@],,}"`.

Other useful modifiers include:

- `a`: Turns paths into absolute paths
- `A`: Turns paths into absolute paths with symlinks resolved
- `s/foo/bar`: Does replacement on each element. Use `gs/foo/bar` for global replacement.
- `&`: Repeat the previous substitution.

### Length 7 Snippet

```
${(i)@}
```

Zsh also supports roughly 30 parameter expansion *flags*.
The `i` flag will sort the parameters case-insensitively.

- `k`: Substitute the array keys instead of values
- `P`: Induce indirect parameter expansion: if `a='b'` and `b='c'`, then `${(P)a}` expands to `'c'`
- `q`: Quote characters special to the shell with backslashes or `$'\NNN'`. `q-` and `q+` will use different methods for quoting.
- `u`: Remove duplicate words in the expansion.
- `z`: Split into words according to shell parsing grammar: if `c='"a b" c'`, then `${(z)c}` will split into `"a b"` `c`.

### Length 8 Snippet

```sh
xy${^a}z
```

With this expression, if `a` is some array (e.g.: `a=(hello world)`),
`a` is converted to a brace expansion (e.g.: `xyhelloz` `xyworldz`

### Length 9 Snippet

```sh
<<<${str}
```

Like in bash, this is a *here-string*.
Unlike in bash, if no command is provided, the string is printed to stdout.
This can often be used as a replacement for `echo`,
except that the expansion of `${str}` occurs in a subshell.

### Length 10 Snippet

```sh
$a[(r)a?*]
```

Array subscripts also have flags! `r` is "reverse subscripting":
This will give the first word in `a` whose value matches `a?*`. (Likewise, `R` gives the last match.)

Other flags include `i` and `I` which *return* the indices or keys of the match,
`k` and `K` which *match* the keys, or `w` or `f` which split scalar `a` on words or lines, respectively.

### Length 11 Snippet

```sh
b=(${@:*a})
```

This is another form of parameter expansion, it will expand to all words of `"$@"` that exist in the array `a`.
Similarly, `${@:|a}` will expand to the words of `$@` which do *not* exist in `a`.

### Length 12 Snippet

```sh
${${(f)s}:h}
```

One of the most powerful features of Zsh is that parameter expansions can be *indefinitely nested*.
So this will take `s`, split it on newlines, and then strip each line's the last path component. (`/usr/bin/zsh` ⇒ `/usr/bin`)

### Length 13 Snippet

```sh
$argv[i,i+10]
```

The numbered parameters `$@` can also be found under the named array `argv`.
For some purposes, this can be more convenient or more consistent if also working with other arrays.

There are two ways to get a substring or non-associative array.
The `${name:offset:length}` method works the same way in Bash,
but the `$name[start,end]` method is different:
The subscripts use *arithmetic expansion*, like you'd find in `$[ ]` or `$(( ))`.

### Length 15 Snippet

```sh
print -P %D{%F}
```

Like Bash's `PS1` sequences, Zsh has its own prompt sequences.
`%D` expands to the current date, with an optional `{`string`}` after it.
That string will be passed to `strftime` to be expanded.

Variables can also be prompt-expanded with the `%` expansion flag: `${(%)foo}`

### Length 16 Snippet

```sh
<<<$[[#16]8#755]
```

Arithmetic expansion supports any base from 2-36 (inclusive).
`n#...` will interpret the number at that base, while `[#n]` will return the number in that base.

The number will be printed as `base#number` (this example: `16#351`) with the exception of certain options and bases:

- `setopt nocbases`: No special cases
- `setopt cbases`: Base 16 numbers will be printed as `0x[num]`
- `setopt cbases octalzeroes`: Base 8 numbers will also be printed as `0[num]`.

With `setopt octalzeroes`, numbers with leading zeroes in arithmetic expansions will be interpreted as octal,
without needing the `8#` prefix.

### Length 19 Snippet

```sh
setopt extendedglob
```

This deserves a post on its own...
This option adds a lot of new globbing options.
It's like changing from EREs to PCREs, but with globs.
I've started submitting `zsh -oextendedglob` as a language for some challenges.

### Length 29 Snippet

```sh
for x y (${a:^^b})c+=$[$#x+y]
```

Okay, there's a lot here. This will:

- `${a:^^b}`: Zip the arrays together, looping the shorter of the two arrays.
- `for x y (...)`: Pull words out two at a time, assigning them to `x` and `y`
- `b+=($[$#x+y])`: Add the length of `x` to the value of `y`, and append that to `c`.

Because only one operation is done for each iteration of the loop, no `{` `}` or `do` `done` is needed.

Answer (score 9):

## ActionScript 3

### Factoid

AS3 is a scripting language designed to be used in client games and applications. It's a fully object oriented language that features dynamic objects that can be changed at run time, just like JavaScript.

### 1-length code

```
7
```

Each number in AS3 is treated as an object.

### 2-length code

```
as
```

AS3 is a strongly typed language; this is how to perform casting.

### 3-length code

```
int
```

This is one of the two number types that AS3 contains. The designers of the language preferred to make it simple and included just two types:

- 64-bit `float` for long values and floating points.
- 32-bit `int` for integers, perhaps for performance.

### 5-length code

```
a:*=1
```

In AS3, functions may have optional values; in this code snippet, 1 is assigned to `a` if no other value been passed to the function. The value after the `:` represents the type of `a`; in this case it's `*`, which means it can have any value. The difference between `*` and `object` is that `*` can also have undefined type. This is how Adobe [explains](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/LiveCycleMosaic/9.0/actionscript/specialTypes.html#*) it:

> When you want to defer type checking to runtime, you can use an untyped property or expression to circumvent compile-time type checking in strict mode. Note, however, that runtime type checking of assignment statements occurs whether you use strict mode or not.

### 9-length-ish code

```
trace("a",0)
```

`trace` is the best logging mechanism ever! You don't need to care about the type you are passing to the `trace` not the number of the params, it will simply print it all back to you, separated with a space char.

Comment: I'm afraid your length-4 code snippet is five characters long?

Comment: @Mauris Shhhh, lets keep it between us ;)

Comment: I coded on AS2 so I dont know if this is still a thing but one of my favorite features of AS2 was the ability to use the `this.` operator when adding code to an object. If I drew a mouse on stage and then selected the mouse and added the code `this.x += 5;` it would move 5 pixels right (as opposed to `stage.layer1.mouse.x += 5;` or whatever it was (It's been like 13 years since I coded in AS2 hahaha)

Answer (score 9):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript)

### Length 6 Snippet

```
r×ß¥l©
```

This looks like gibberish so here's the ungolfed version: `r(x)m(#$P(l))`.

This returns a list of first `n` numbers and if they are prime. An output for the input `5` would be: `false,false,true,true,false`

### Length 4 Snippet

```
£lc)
```

Now we're getting somewhere. This loops through each character of the input and replaces the character with it's character code.

### Length 3 Snippet

```
¥x)
```

Checks if the input is prime. Returns `true` or `false` respectively.

### Length 2 Snippet

```
xv
```

`x` is the input, `v` is a function which will reverse x. This essentially reverses the input.

### Length 1 Snippet

```
M
```

The `M` character is preset to return a random number

---

[Try any of these online](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/)

#### Factoid:

TeaScript was born after I got fed up with JavaScript's incredibly long `String.fromCharCode` function. It was originally made to have just shortened property names but TeaScript has grown quickly.

Answer (score 9):

## haxe

[Haxe](http://haxe.org/) is a neat language that lets you target a lot of major platforms with the same codebase - desktop, mobile, web, server, anything.

Finding good examples for the first couple of votes will be hard, so bear with me :)

## 1

```
.
```

Dot is the operator to access class fields and methods, object properties, or enum properties.

## 2

```
[]
```

This is an empty array. More on arrays (array comprehension) later.

## 3

```
3*9
```

Multiplication. The compiler is smart enough to change that into 27 in the resulting code, even in less strict languages (e.g. JS).

## 5

```
0...9
```

This is a shortcut to create an `IntIterator`, which will produce the numbers 0 to 8 (inclusive).

```
for (i in 42...45) Sys.println(i);
```

Produces

```
42
43
44
```

Answer (score 9):

## JSFuck

### Length 6

```
+[![]]
```

Since `![]` is `false`, `[![]].toString()` is `"false"`, which isn't a valid number. Therefore, when converting to number, it returns `NaN`.

I decide to make it here because it's the first time we can create an uppercase letter, and uppercase letter usually take a lot of code to generate.

### Length 5

```
+!+[]
```

As mentioned before (in the length 4 section), `!+[]` produces `true`. Also, as mentioned before (in the length 1 section), `+` can cast to number.

Therefore, this code casts `true` to number, which is `1`.

This snippet can be chained indefinitely to produce any number you want.

For example, `2` would be `+!+[]+!+[]`, and `3` would be `+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]`.

As mentioned before (in the length 4 section), `+!![]` is also valid.

### Length 4

```
!+[]
```

The operation `!` casts to boolean.

The number `0`, the empty string `""`, the `undefined`, and the `NaN` are all treated as `false`.

Other objects are treated as `true`.

Unlike Python, the empty array `[]` and the empty [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals) `{}` are treated as `true`.

Therefore, this is the shortest snippet to produce `true`. It is equivalent to `!0`.

`!![]` would also work.

### Length 3

```
+[]
```

As mentioned before, `+` casts to integer. In this case, it would be evaluated to `0`.

However, also as mentioned before, `+` can join two arrays to form a string.

Therefore, `+[]+[]` is really `0+[]` which would produce `"0"`.

### Length 2

```
++
```

There are really only `36` length-2 snippets.

Out of the `36` snippets, I chose this one.

This is the shortest way to add `1` to a number.

This function is very strange.

For example, `v=1; ++v` works, but `++1` does not.

For example, `v=[]; ++v` also works (empty array `[]` is implicitly cast to `0`), but `++[]` does not.

To make it work in JSFuck, you would have to type `++[[]][+[]]` instead.

`[[]][+[]]` is really `[[]][0]`, which is an empty array `[]`.

Why `++[[]][+[]]` works but not `++[]` is yeond me.

### Length 1

```
+
```

`+` can convert a string to a number, as well as adding two arrays together to form a string. For example, `+"0"` would result in the number `0`, and `[1]+[0]` will result in the string `"10"`.

### Factoid

All JSFuck programs are valid Javascript programs. However, JSFuck aims to use only 6 operators to do everything: `+![]()`. Also, its name is derived from JS (javascript) and Brainfuck. Brainfuck only uses 8 operators.

Comment: It's not strange; increment only works on variables.

Comment: Why is `[[]][+[]]` a variable but not `[]`?

Comment: @LeakyNun I'm guessing there, but isn't `[[]][+[]]` technichally the *value* in an array's cell? hence, it's technichally a variable, alllowing to increment it.

Comment: @Katenkyo Thanks, but I still don't get it. What is `[]` then?

Comment: @LeakyNun it is an array in itself, in some cases JS will allow you to use it as a pointer to its first value in the second case, you get an empty array, yes, but it is interpreted as a value as it is inside an other array -> `[[]][0]` vs `[]`.
In first case you have the value of an array wich is considered a variable of type "array", in the second one, you manipulate an array.

Comment: `[]` is not a variable, it's a value/literal. e.g. `a` or `a[0]` or `a.a` is a variable, `1` or `true` or `'foo''` or `{foo: 'bar'}` is not.

Comment: Make more please

Comment: Is `[][[]]` the 6th?

Answer (score 9):

## Scratch

Factoid: Scratch has a great appeal to younger audiences, with the large majority of new accounts being from 10 to 16 years old.

#### 1 block

[image: Say]
The `say` block takes what is in the text space and outputs it as a text bubble.

#### 2 blocks

[image: Start & Stop]
The `when green flag clicked` block is essential for most programs.  The `stop [all/this script/other scripts in sprite]` block does exactly what it says, but it isn't used much in optimized scripts.

Comment: The [highest-ranked scoring rule you linked to](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5013/13950) scores the `say` block as four bytes `say(` plus the contents.

Comment: Although since it does not specify a human-language for scratchBlock output, you can also use `decir(` or `说(` or lots of other options...

Comment: I'm going off the main post, not the responses.

Comment: ... but that's not how meta works.  However, it makes sense to use "each block is one vote" for the purposes here.

Comment: And each character of text in text spaces is one vote.  Don't forget about that.

Answer (score 8):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com)

Hassium is an object oriented programming language in C#. It contains many of the exact C# classes and over 400 functions built in. You can run Hassium code and examples [here](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium).

### Length 1

```
5
```

This is a constant integer in Hassium.

### Length 2

```
a:
```

This is a label in Hassium. Hassium supports labels and gotos as well as all types of loops.

### Length 3

```
m()
```

This is a call to a function called `m` in Hassium.

### Length 4

```
a=4;
```

This is declaring the variable a with the initial value of 4. In Hassium you don't have to declare the type of variable like `int a=4;`

### Length 5

```
a=[];
```

This declares a new array in Hassium, where arrays are Javascript and python like. From here I could do a.add(), etc.

### Length 6

```
use IO
```

This imports the IO module into the global namespace, which contains sever different classes including File, Directory, and Path. Hassium as a whole has several of these builtin modules with countless classes.

### Length 7

```
print()
```

This is the most simple function in Hassium, the print() function which takes in a string and displays it to the console without a trailing newline. print() is one of the functions that is in the global namespace, and not in a class or module.

Answer (score 8):

## [ShapeScript](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/ShapeScript)

#### Length 6 snippet

```
"%c"@%
```

ShapeScript has no type casts, but Python's `%` can be used to work around this limitation. This snippet, e.g., pops an integer from the stack and pushes the singleton string of the corresponding Unicode character in return.

#### Length 5 snippet

```
'"A"'
```

This is a string that, when evaluated, pushes the singleton string **A** on the stack. There is no way to escape a quote in ShapeScript, so two different kinds of quotes are required to use strings in evaluated strings.

#### Length 4 snippet

```
01-?
```

This calculates **-1** and then pushes a copy (`?`) of the bottom-most item on top of the stack. Since there are no variables, leaving things on the bottom to access them later is a common technique.

#### Length 3 snippet

```
123
```

Despite what it may look like, this actually pushes *three* integers on the stack. Any integer above **9** or below **0** has to be pushed as angebraic sum of products of integers.

#### Length 2 snippet

```
*!
```

With a Boolean and a string on the stack, `*` pushes the unmodified string for *True* and and empty string for *False*, which `!` then evaluates. This is the closest ShapeScript has to a conditional operator.

#### Length 1 snippet

```
!
```

Discounting that it can no longer take input, this is a fully compliant ShapeScript interpreter.

#### Factoid

I created ShapeScript as one half of my submission to [Create a programming language that only appears to be unusable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62064) as a simple, stack-based language with a simple syntax.

While ShapeScript is far from unusable, it does not have traditional loops, conditionals or variables, can modify only the two topmost stack items, can modify strings only using split and join, etc.

Answer (score 8):

## [O](https://github.com/phase/o)

### Factoid

O is a programming language inspired by GolfScript, Pyth, K, and tons of other languages. It was made by Phase (me) over the summer of 2015, so it is relatively new. The interpreter was originally written in Java, but development has recently switched to a C interpreter. [Here are some examples of the language](http://o.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/).

## Length 5

```
'69+o
```

This programs prints `69`.

- `'6` pushes `6` as a string

  - `'` pushes the next character in the program as a string to the stack
  - `6` is the next character, so it gets pushes as a string
- `9` pushes the number *9* to the stack
- `+` adds the top two elements of the stack. Since of them is a string, they get concatenated.
- `o` outputs the result

## Length 4

```
M]+o
```

This program gets the sum of all the digits of the input number. (`1234` = `1 + 2 + 3 + 4` = `10`)

- `M` is a builtin macro that calls `[i~`.

  - `[` Starts an array (which really acts like another stack)
  - `i` Gets an input from stdin and pushes it to the stack (the array in this case)
  - `~` Evaluates the top of the stack (the input) as O code, which pushes each digit of the input number to the stack.
- `]` Closes the array, pushes it to the stack
- `+` Folds the array by adding all the elements together
- `o` Outputs the sum of the digits to stdout.

It's a pretty complicated program for only being 4 bytes!

### Length 3

```
{1}
```

O supports CodeBlocks like GolfScript and CJam. This is a CodeBlock that pushes the number *1* to the stack when it is run. Just creating a CodeBlock pushes the block itself to the stack, without running it. We could assign it to a variable, or use `~` to run it.

### Length 2

```
Ao
```

`A` pushes *10* to the stack. `o` pops the top of the stack and outputs it to *STDOUT*. This program outputs *10* to the screen.

### Length 1

```
1
```

Any number literal will be pushed to the stack as an integer. The stack is not outputted when the code ends ([though this may change soon!](https://github.com/phase/o/issues/35)), so the program exits without outputting anything.

Answer (score 8):

### [Cookie](https://github.com/Ojas-Gulati/cookie)

Cookie is still in development, so these may not work!

**Factoid:** Cookie's name is inspired by @Dennis Jelly, and I wanted to keep with the sweet food thing. However, I forgot browser cookies, and you will be unable to find it on Github easily.

Cookie is stack oriented, and uses Javascript - specifically Node.js

**1 byte snippet:**

```
p
```

Checks if the number is prime, and outputs true or false.

I was really tempted to also add these two snippets:

```
c
```

and

```
C
```

Both do similar things. `s` converts a character to a ASCII number, while `S` does the reverse.

**2 byte snippet:**

```
))
```

Yup, it's a double increment. `)` increments the stack value by one.

**3 byte snippet**

```
wJ"
```

Not much here. `w` starts a write and `"` closes it, so `J` is written.

A polite request, please don't ask me why I chose J. :P

Comment: An unbalanced parenthesis will stay with you all day...

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I have a lot of that in Cookie. :P

Answer (score 8):

## [IPOS](https://github.com/DenkerAffe/IPOS)

#### Factoid

IPOS is a stack-based golfing-language for string processing. An IPOS program places it's input on the stack at the start and prints the concatenated stack contents at the end. This has the nice side-effect that a zero byte IPOS program is equivalent to a basic cat-program.

#### Length 1

```
L
```

IPOS has a set of [predefined variables](https://github.com/DenkerAffe/IPOS/wiki/Variables). This program pushes the value of the variable `L` to the stack which is the alphabet in lowercase letters. Remember that any input string gets placed on the stack initially. So this program appends the lowercase alphabet to the input and prints it.

#### Length 2

```
SA
```

This program takes a string with space-separated words and sorts them in ascening order. For example the input `Programming Puzzles & Code Golf` yields the result `& Code Golf Programming`.

**How this works**
The input string is already placed at the stack. We push a space (variable `S`) to the stack and apply the command `A` which splits the input on spaces, sorts the resulting substrings in ascending order and joins the result back on spaces.

#### Length 3

```
'A=
```

As mentioned in the first program, IPOS has a set of predefined variables. If you want to define a custom variable, you can do that with the `=` command. It creates a new variable with the name given in the top stack item and assigns the value given by the stack item below that.

Variable names can only be one character long. Also they overwrite the original meaning of this character which means that we can no longer use `A` for sorting as we did in the program with length 2.

So this program simply takes the input and saves it in a variable named `A`. Since you usually need this value right away, `=` also leaves the assigned value on the stack, so the output of this program is identical to the input.

#### Length 4

```
P!r%
```

This program takes an input string and reverses each substring between dots. So the input `abc.def.ghij` yields `jihg.fed.cba`.

Straight to the code breakdown this time:

```
P!r%

P      # Push a dot '.', one of the predefined variables.
 !r    # Push a command that reverses a string
   %   # Split the input on dots, apply the reverse command to every substring 
       # and join the resulting substring back on dots.
```

This shows one of the commands for functional programming. Those make use of command objects that are basically strings which get treated as IPOS code. They can be created like normal strings, but instead of quotes, we use backticks for them. To create a command object with only one command we can just put a `!` before it.

#### Length 5

```
S'+Re
```

This program takes a string of space seperated numbers and outputs their sum. Pretty simple task, but the way it does that is quite interesting.

IPOS does not have any builtins for math operations besides simple incrementing and decrementing. It is still a language for string processing, so I didn't see a reason to include those. However, we can make use of the eval command `e` to do some basic math. This command takes a string and performs the numeric calculations in it using Python syntax.

You might already suspect where this is going. The above program simply replaces spaces with pluses by pushing a space and a plus character and applying the replace command `R` to them and the input. The resulting string then gets evaluated by `e` which yields the expected result.

#### Length 6

```
S`2<`%
```

This program takes a string of space separated words and removes all but the first two characters from them.
We are using `%` again here which splits the input on a given character (here space), applies a set of commands to each part and joins the parts back. As mentioned above, command objects can be created just like a string, but are enclosed in backticks. The command we are applying to each part here is `2<` which takes the first two characters of a string and discards the rest.

#### Length 7

```
SC/eCPj
```

This program takes a string followed by a space and a number, splits the string into that many pieces and joins the result back on dots.

```
SC       # Split input on spaces
  /      # Swap the two top stack items so the number is on top
   e     # Convert the number into an integer
    C    # Split the string into pieces and pushe the substrings to the stack
     Pj  # Join the whole stack on dots
```

Answer (score 8):

## WireMod Expression 2

#### Length 1

```
#
```

This a comment in E2.

#### Length 2

```
?:
```

E2 supports a the ternary operator. Really useful.

#### Length 5

```
#[ ]#
```

E2's multiline comments are formatted as such

#### Factoid

[Expression 2](http://wiki.wiremod.com/wiki/Expression_2) is a programming language inside Lua, inside a game.
(Page takes a while to load)

Comment: (belated) Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 8):

## [Racket](http://racket-lang.org)

We have Clojure (the Java among LISPs), and Common Lisp (C), but where are Scheme (x86 asm) and <s>more</s> most importantly Racket (Python)?? :o

Racket is like the Python of LISPs. Common Lisp seems old (it's older than FORTRAN!), and Scheme seems boring, academic, and comes with a too-sparse standard library.

On the other hand, Racket is a batteries-included, industry-ready Scheme, that's fun to learn and use every day.

#### Factoid

In most other LISPs, `()` is the empty list. However, Racket's syntax is minorly deviant in that `'()` is the empty list and `()` is an illegal empty application (that is, the application of nothing to nothing, which makes no sense).

#### Length 1

```
λ
```

Other people have been counting *chars* not *bytes* so I'll use this two byte unicode glyph: `U+03BB GREEK SMALL LETTER LAMBDA`. This is synonymous with the `lambda` keyword for creating anonymous functions, which is *excellent* for golf because otherwise, you'd need to `(define (name args...) exprs...)` which is longer. (Of course, Racket isn't very golfy otherwise.)

#### Length 2

```
#f
```

False. `#t` is for true, and so is everything that's not `#f`, much like other functional languages, and much to the dismay of every imperative programmer ever.

#### Length 3

```
let
```

Another keyword. (Still no executable code.) This one is an integral part of any LISP; it lets us define local variables and procedures.

A let form looks like:

```
(let ([a 1]
      [b 2])
    (displayln a)  ;; 1
    (displayln b)) ;; 2
(displayln a)      ;; error, a is not defined
```

Or like:

```
(let loop ([a 1])
    (displayln a)
    (loop (+ 1 a)))
```

That counts up forever, and will not cause a stack overflow because Racket is tail-recursive, like any compliant Scheme.

#### Length 4

```
cadr
```

One of my favourite things about Racket is this:

[image]

Now, `car` is the LISPism for Current Address Register, or the first item of a pair. LISP lists are singly linked lists like so:

```
'(1 2 3)
;; is actually
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 null)))
(car cdr = (car cdr = (car cdr = null))) 
;; i.e.
struct Node { int data; Node* next; };
```

Each item in the list is actually some data, and (a pointer to)another list, which is (a pointer to)another list, which is a... yeah.

To get the `cdr` (Current Decrement Register) of a given cons cell you use... the `cdr` function.

How to get the second item in a list? `(car (cdr xs))`. Or: `cadr`.

How to get the third item in a list? `(car (cdr (cdr xs)))`. Or: `caddr`.

How to get the fourth item in a list? `(car (cdr (cdr (cdr xs))))`. Or: `cadddr`.

See where this is going? Not often are these actually used over numeric indexing, but they are  very handy.

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to contain code in your factoid.

Comment: @Cyo I don't think demonstrating how the empty list differs from the empty application is substantial code by this question's definition, but you're free to disagree

Comment: Fair enough. Still something interesting  that wouldn't fit well into the snippet format, so I can see why you put it there

Answer (score 8):

### GNU Octave

Snippet 7:

```
disp(j)
 0 + 1i
```

Prints j out to the screen without the ans = overhead

Snippet 6:

```
[i](1)
ans =  0 + 1i
```

This generates an instance of a **scalar** only containing sqrt(-1), takes the first element of it (a complex number), and prints it out. A scalar is basically an array.

Snippet 3:

```
{3}
ans = 
{
  [1,1] =  3
}
```

This generates an instance of a matrix with one entry, 3.

Snippet 2:

```
[]
ans = [](0x0)
```

This is just a simple empty array.
Snippet 1:

```
j
ans =  0 + 1i
```

Yes, Octave understands i or j as the square root of -1!

Factoid: Octave is free and approximately 80% compatible with Matlab! (except toolboxes)

Comment: ... I can't believe this doesn't already exist. Nice job creating it!

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ, [Well, it does](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77826/31516). =)

Comment: @Stewie Griffin: Is that ok that I've got an another Entry?

Comment: The question says: It is suggested that you choose a programming language that has not been posted already but this is not a requirement.", so it's OK for you to have another Octave entry. Personally, I suggest you don't use any of the features that's already covered in my (and possibly flawr's answers).

Comment: Well, I won't update it. Should I delete it?

Comment: Why not update it? I was just suggesting you don't use anything that has already been showcased from MATLAB/Octave. New stuff can be interesting though! =)

Comment: OK, I will update!

Comment: `{3}` creates a 1-by-1 cell array with a 1-by-1 matrix with the value, `3` in it. Creating a 1-by-1 cell array rarely has any pros, only cons. But the brackets can be used to create cell arrays with more elements too of course: `{3, rand(3,2); 'This is a string in a cell', magic(4)}`, in which case it's very useful.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Huh.I'm  not so experienced with Octave/MATLAB...

Comment: _This generates an instance of a matrix with one entry, 3._ The way to do this exact task is simply one byte: `3`! =) Try `x = 3; y={3}; whos`. You'll see that `x` is a 1-by-1 double, where as `y` is a 1-by-1 cell. `y = {'This is a cell'}` will also result in a 1-by-1 cell. `whos y{1}` will show that that specific cell element contains a 1-by-14 array of chars. You can't do y = {3}, followed by `y==3` or `y+3` if `y`is a cell, since they're not of the same class.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Oh. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

## [Tellurium](https://m654z.github.io/Tellurium)

**Factoid**

Tellurium is an esoteric, tape-based programming language written by me in Python. It's mainly intended for use in code-golf challenges, but it pretty much failed at that task.

**Length 1 snippet**

```
^
```

`^` is the output/print command. It outputs whatever is in the selected cell, which, in the above snippet, is 0. (0 is the default value)

**Length 2 snippet**

```
i^
```

This is a simple cat program (a program that copies its input to its output). `i` takes input and puts it in the selected cell. As you probably remember, `^` outputs whatever is in the selected cell.

(I promise that there will be more interesting snippets later on. There's not much you can do with two commands)

**Length 3 snippet**

```
I§^
```

This snippet calculates the factorial of the input and displays it.

`I` gets input and converts it to an integer. `§` calculates the factorial, and stores the result in the selected cell.

There are numerous other math-related one character builtins, for example:

`I½^` calculates the exponent of the input

`Iq^` calculates the square root of the input

**Length 4 snippet**

```
{p}f
```

This is an anonymous function that does... nothing.

In Tellurium, you can create an anonymous function by using the syntax `{code}f`. The function can then be called using the command `ä`.

`p` is a placeholder command, the equivalent to the Python statement `pass`.

**Length 5 snippet**

```
[I|^;
```

This snippet uses a loop to output `0` *n* times. The syntax for a loop in Tellurium is `[times|code;`. If `I` is in the `times` section, it will run the code *input* times.

**Length 6 snippet**

```
µHi!~^
```

Finally, something more interesting. This snippet outputs `Hi!`. The syntax for inserting text into the selected cell is a bit strange: `µ(text)~`.

**Length 7 snippet**

```
¤h|Hey]
```

This snippet showcases variables. Again, the syntax is a bit strange: `¤(name)|(value)]`. In this case, it stores "Hey" in the variable `h`.

To display that variable, use `;h.^`.

Answer (score 8):

### CSS (Cascading Style Sheets)

Somebody's already done a CSS answer, but here's another one. I promise to make the one-char snippet exactly the same. :)

---

#### 6 chars

```
:hover
```

This is an example of a *pseudo-class*, which is basically the state of an element. The `:hover` pseudo-class applies when the element is being hovered over; some others are `:active` (mouse button down), `:valid`/`:invalid` (form/input is valid/invalid), and `:target` (element is target of current `#hash-portion-of-url`).

Pseudo-classes can also take arguments, for example `:not(some-other-selector)` and the `:nth-child` family: `:nth-child`, `:nth-last-child`, `:nth-of-type`, and `:nth-last-of-type`.

---

#### 5 chars

```
--foo
```

CSS variables, properly known as *custom properties*, function like variables in other languages, only a bit more

```
c
 a
  s
   c
    a
     d
      i
       n
        g
```

to fit in better with the nature of CSS. Variables are used like this:

```
:root {
  --foo: goldenrod;
}

.some-element {
  background-color: var(--foo);
}

.another-element {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 3px solid var(--foo);
}
```

and `var(--foo)` is replaced with the value of `--foo`.

However, because these variables are parsed at runtime, not as a compilation step in a preprocessor such as [Sass](http://sass-lang.com) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org), they can be used more dynamically. For example:

```
:root { --foo: red }
body:hover { --foo: blue }
p { color: var(--foo) }
```

This will make the text in `<p>` (paragraph) elements red, except when the `<body>` is hovered, in which case the text will turn blue.

---

#### 4 chars

```
42cm
```

As well as the `px` (pixels), `em` (relative to font size), `rem` (relative to font size of root element), `vh` (1/100 of viewport height), and `vw` (1/100 of viewport width) units, which are usually what you use, CSS also has physical units for `cm`, `mm`, and `in`.  The only problem is that they don't necessarily represent physical centimetres, millimetres, and inches, but (device-dependent) may be relative to the assumption that 1 inch = 96px. Anyway, it's usually better to use relative units like `em` and `rem` instead.

---

#### 3 chars

```
-o-
```

Browser prefixes allow browsers to implement WIP standards before they've been finalised. The idea is that if the spec changes, the old implementation's behind a prefix so the correct implementation can be done without the prefix. However, browsers are moving away from prefixes in favour of flags set by the user in the browser (`chrome://flags` in Chrome and `about:config` in Firefox), as prefixes have caused headaches when trying to ensure compatibility with old browsers.

The prefix shown above is for Opera (before it switched to using the Blink rendering engine); the other prefixes are:

- `-webkit-` for WebKit/Blink (Chrome, Opera, Safari)
- `-moz-` for Gecko (Firefox)
- `-ms-` for *that thing*.

Prefixes are used like this:

```
.foo {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(30deg);
          transform: rotateZ(30deg);
}
```

They can also be used on selectors and property values.

---

#### 2 chars

```
//
```

People ask why CSS doesn't have `//` comments. Well it does. Sort of.

In [this blog post](http://www.xanthir.com/b4U10), Tab Atkins talks about using `//` comments in CSS. They don't function as line comments, but rather *"next construct comments"*. This means that these are equivalent:

```
foo {
  color: white;
  // font-weight: bold;
  background-color: black;
}

// bar {
  width: 12rem;
}

// @keyframes baz {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

and

```
foo {
  color: white;
  /* font-weight: bold; */
  background-color: black;
}

/* bar {
  width: 12rem;
} */

/* @keyframes baz {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
} */
```

There are also some weird tricks like using a `@comment {  }` block to simulate nested comments.

---

#### 1 char

```
*
```

The star hack. Sample usage:

```
.foo {
  background-color: lightgray; /* displayed by most browsers */
  *background-color: red; /* displayed by IE <= 7 */
}
```

---

**Factoid:** some web servers originally served `.css` files as `application/x-pointplus`, to do with presentation software, instead of `text/css`.

Answer (score 8):

## [Unipants' Golfing Language](https://github.com/schas002/Unipants-Golfing-Language)

### Factoid

UGL only has 16 operations, a stack, registers, ifs and whiles to do things. But even if these supplies are to spare, anything may be possible if you do things smart enough... or not? ;-)

---

### Length 5 snippet

```
IlOI:
```

[Try it online!](http://schas002.github.io/Unipants-Golfing-Language/?code=SWxPSTo&input=SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ)

This is the cat program. As you see, it is a translation of the brainfuck program `,[.,]`.

`I` captures one character, so it is the same as `,` in bf. `O` prints one character, so it is the same as `.` in bf. And `l` and `:` enclose a while loop, that works the same as `[` and `]` in bf (while the top of stack is non zero).

### Length 2 snippet

```
io
```

[Try it online!](http://schas002.github.io/Unipants-Golfing-Language/?code=aW8&input=NTEy)

This program reads and writes an integer. And guess it, it can be any length. `i` is greedy, meaning it will catch as long an integer as possible.

### Length 1 snippet

```
s
```

[Try it online!](http://schas002.github.io/Unipants-Golfing-Language/?code=cw)

This program sets the current register number to zero. First, let me show you an excerpt of the README for registers:

> #### Registers
>
> - `r` - load the value in current register
> - `R` - save the value in current register
> - `s` - set current register number to top of stack

If the stack is empty, the current register number is set to zero.

Answer (score 8):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ)

I'm trying to teach QuickBasic to do codegolf (and myself in the process), so I'm creating the language Quick Basic Interpreter for Codegolf, or QBIC for short.

**0 byte factoid**

Most of QBIC's strength lies in just making a shorthand for QBasic's expansive syntax, but I've also incorporated several features of my own. When generating the trans-compiled BAS file, a standard header is imported that implements some of these features. For instance, the numbers 1 through 10 get initialised as variables `q` through `z`. This occasionally saves me some bytes when initialising a FOR loop, and shaves a byte off of using `10`.

**1 byte**

```
}
```

The above statement will do ... exactly nothing. When found in the QBIC code, it wil automatically add END IF's, NEXTs and LOOPs for every opened IF/FOR/DO construct it finds (in the correct order, naturally). Note that `]` does the same for one language construct, where `}` closes all opened constructs.

However, since we've not yet opened any of those constructs, this does nothing and results in an 'empty' Qbasic BAS file. Also, at the end of compiling QBIC, the compiler will run this statement automatically.

**2 bytes**

```
?z
```

This will write 10 on the screen. In QBIC, the letters of the lower-case alphabet are references to numerical variables. This is retained from QBasic, where `PRINT a` would give me a `0` on the screen (even without ever defining `a`). In addition, QBIC initialises q-z to be 1 through 10 by default. The `?` is obviously shorthand for the `PRINT` statement and writes to screen.

**3 bytes**

```
_Xb
```

`_X` can be used to terminate a program, and when used with a suffix, it will print something on exit. Suffixes can be A-Z (which refers to string variables A$ - Z$) or lowercase a-z (for the numerical vars of this name). The example snippet ends the program, and prints variable `b` to screen before it turns off the lights.

**4 bytes**

```
?_r|
```

`_r` is a random number generator. By itself, it will generate a random number between 0 and 10 and, in this case, print it. We can also add one or two parameters for a different lower and upper bound; If only one is specified, that's our new upper bound.
`_r20|` will generate a number between 0 and 20.
`_r5,18|` will generate a number between 5 and 18. 
The statement `_R` is equivalent to `_r` with one exception: `_R` assigns to a variable, `_r` does not:

```
?_r|    PRINT getNextRandomNumber(0, 10)
_R|?a   a = getNextRandomNumber(0, 10) : PRINT a
```

**5 bytes**

```
:_Ra|
```

The above snippet introduces the `:`, which reads the first unread command line parameter and assigns it to the first available numeric var. The resulting QBasic code for this snippet is:

```
a = assignCMDToNum!
b = getRandomNumber(0, a)
```

There's also `;`, which does the same for string variables.

**6 bytes**

```
?!z$+A
```

Here, we see a cast in action. QBasic is kinda picky when it comes to data types. Adding a string to an integer will result in errors. To work around this, I've added a casting function. The above snippet will print `10` (`z` is auto-initialised to `10`) and append whatever is in the variable `A$`. For instance, a full program could be

```
#test`?!z$+A
```

and the result then is `10test`.

Casting is done using the `!` symbol. It then casts everything between the `!` and the delimiter. Usually `|` is the delimiter for variable-length arguments, but CAST uses either a `$` to perform the cast from number to string, or another `!` to cast a string to number.

**7 bytes**

```
Z=_f_tA
```

Lot going on here. Let's work on the assumption that `A$` already holds a value, say "  Hello  " (significant spaces). This snippet then sets `Z$` to the reversed (`_f`), trimmed (`_t`) version of `A$`, `olleH` and prints it to the screen.

- The behaviour between `_f` and `_F` is different: `_F` declares a variable and assigns its output to it, `_f` only gives the output and assigning is done by other parts of the script. The same goes for `_r` in my 5-byte snippet. This is called **ULX**, or Upper-Lowercase Extension. Whether or not output gets auto-assigned is one of the behavioural changes ULX can bring, but there are other examples. `_D`, for intance, yields the system date, `_d` yelds system time. Both don't auto-assign.
- `_t` removes the whitespace on both sides of its argument. `_u` does a left-trim, `_v` does right-trim. All three support ULX, and for all three this switches between auto-assign (uppercase) or output only (lowercase).
- Both `_f` and `_t` should be delimited with `|` to signify the end of the parameter list. However, since EOF is reached, the correct number of `|`'s get added to close all opened parameter lists. If this statement would have been followed by the closing commands for language constructs (`]`or `}`, see byte 1) those same `|`'s would get added.
- QBIC allows for the result of one function to be the input for the next: `_f` takes as input the result of `_t`
- Finally, if we would run this program, it would actually print `olleH`, despite we never use a `?` or `_X*` statement. This is because QBIC implicitly prints the contents of Z$ on exit.

Summarizing, the above 7-byte snippet would roughly compile into this QBasic block:

```
FUNCTION revstring$(in$)
  ... function definition imported through QBIC.H
END FUNCTION 

... we set A$ to be "  Hello  "

Z$ = revstring$(LTRIM$(RTRIM$(A$)))

PRINT Z$
```

**8 bytes**

Let's look at literals. There are 2 types in QBIC: String literals (Verbal and Silent) and Code Literals. They are started with `@`, `#` and `'` respectively, are terminated with ```. Using a `&boxul;` respresents a line-break.

````
?@check`  --> Verbal string literal: Defines A$ in the header, assign the value "check" 
              to it, and insert A$ in the body of the resulting QBasic at this moment. 
#10`?A+A  --> Silent literal: Defines the literal A$ as "10", but doesn't insert `A$` 
              in the QBasic output at this time. This sample then prints "1010"; `+`in 
              this context is string concatenation.
'SQR(9)`  --> Code literal: from the `'`(which would be seen as a comment by QBasic) to
              the ``` is not stored as a variable, but passed unaltered to the resulting 
              QBasic. This particular statement calculates the root of 9.
````

Answer (score 8):

## [Fourier](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fourier)

### Factoid

I originally intended this to be a golfing version of Brainfuck... Alas, due to the simplicity of the language structure, this language [is in no way good for golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55879/30525).

### Snippets

#### Length 0 Snippet:

An empty program does nothing. No input, no output, no change to the accumulator.

[**Try it online!**](http://fourier.tryitonline.net)

---

#### Length 1 Snippet:

```
o
```

`o` outputs the value of the accumulator. Since the value of the accumulator is 0 at the start of the program, 0 is outputted.

[**Try it online!**](http://fourier.tryitonline.net/#code=bw)

---

#### Length 2 Snippet:

```
^o
```

`^` increases the value of the accumulator by one. The `o` then outputs the value of the accumulator, printing the number 1.

[**Try it online!**](http://fourier.tryitonline.net/#code=Xm8)

---

#### Length 3 Snippet:

```
9ro
```

`r` generates a random number between 0 and the value pf the accumulator. Here, it generates a random number between 0 and nine and then `o` outputs the number.

[**Try it online!**](http://fourier.tryitonline.net/#code=OXJv)

---

#### Length 4 Snippet:

```
4^do
```

Uses the fifth function of the date function: outputting the current year. The other functions of the date function are:

- **0**: current second
- **1**: current minute
- **2**: current hour
- **3**: current day
- **4**: current month
- **5**: current year

[**Try it online!**](http://fourier.tryitonline.net/#code=NF5kbw)

---

### Length 5 snippet:

```
I*10o
```

Sets the value of the accumulator the user's input, multiplies it by ten and outputs the number. It's a basic program but demonstrates how user input works.

[**Try it online!**](http://fourier.tryitonline.net/#code=SSoxMG8&input=NTA)

---

### Length 6 snippet:

```
2(5ro)
```

This program prints random numbers until the random number is 2. It is an example of looping:

```
x(code here)
```

Repeats the code within the brackets until the resulting value of the accumulator within the brackets is equal to the value of the accumulator at position `x`.

[**Try it online!**](http://fourier.tryitonline.net/#code=Mig1cm8p&input=)

---

### Length 7 snippet:

```
|7o|GGG
```

This is an example of a function. It works like so:

```
|code here|x
```

You contain the function code within the pipes and store the function in the variable `x` (can be any variable name). To run the code within the pipes, just write the function name.

The function here prints the number 7 twice because `g` (the function name) is called twice.

[**Try it on FourIDE!**](https://labs.turbo.run/beta/fourIDE/editor/?code=fDdvfEdHRw)

---

### Length 8 snippet:

```
I^~NN%2o
```

This is a simple program which takes an input of a single number and tells you if the number is even (1) or not (0).

It is an example of how Fourier uses 1 and 0 as truthy and falsey values.

[**Try it online!**](http://fourier.tryitonline.net/#code=SV5-Tk4lMm8&input=Ng)

Answer (score 8):

## Racket

**Factoid** : A programmable programming language: Racket is a full-spectrum programming language. It goes beyond Lisp and Scheme with dialects that support objects, types, laziness, and more. (https://racket-lang.org/)

(I am surprised no one has added Racket till now).

Functions or procedures need to be in parentheses. First term in parentheses is procedure name, rest are its arguments. If an argument is a procedure, it has to be in its own brackets. Values (non-procedures) are written without brackets.

Main syntax difference between Java and Racket is f(a, b) vs (f a b), x+y+z vs (+ x y z), x == y vs (eq? x y) and x=2 vs (define x 2), or if already defined, (set! x 2). There is no need to declare types like public static void or int char string etc.

### Length 1

```
i
```

Prints value of i.

Also: + - / * are functions:

```
(+ 1 2 3 4)
```

Output: 10 (all numbers are added together)

```
(* 1 2 3 4)
```

Output: 24 (product of all numbers)

```
(/ 20 5 2)
```

Output: 2 (20 is divided by 5 as well as 2)

```
(- 10 5 2)
```

Output: 3 (5 and 2 are subtracted from 10)

### Length 2

```
pi
```

Prints value of pi:

```
3.141592653589793
```

### Length 3

```
let
```

For local binding as in:

```
(let ( (x 5)   (y 10) )
  (println  (* x y))
)
; x and y are not visible here;
```

Also:

```
map
```

Subjects each item of a list to the sent function, e.g. to double every item of the list:

```
(map    (lambda(x) (* 2 x))    (list 1 2 3) )
```

Output:

```
'(2 4 6)
```

Also:

```
for
```

Standard for loop as well as its extensions:

```
for* for/list for/sum for/product for/first for/last for/and for/or
```

There are more extensions https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html !

### Length 4

Conditionals:

```
cond
```

For example (from https://docs.racket-lang.org/racket-cheat/index.html):

```
(cond 
  [(even? x) 0] 
  [(odd? x) 1] 
  [else "impossible!"])
```

Also

```
list
```

Being derived from Lisp & Scheme, list is very important data structure here:

```
(list 1 "a" #\a (list 1 2 3))
```

### Length 5

```
match
```

Match is like case-switch:

```
(match x
  [3 (displayln "x is 3")]
  [4 (displayln "x is 4")]
  [5 (displayln "x is 5")]
  [default (displayln "none of the above")])
```

Also:

```
apply
```

This opens a list and provides all elements to the function, for example:

```
(apply + (list 1 2 3 4 5))
```

becomes:

```
(+ 1 2 3 4 5) ; => 15
```

### Length 6

Define: a very basic function- to assign value to a variable:

```
(define s "A string")
(define n 10)
```

Also:
printf - the print function:

```
(printf "~a ; ~a ~n" s n)
```

Output:

```
A string ; 10
```

Also: Filter - a function that filters a list for items which give true value to the specified function (sent as an argument):

```
> (filter string? (list "a" "b" 6))
'("a" "b")
> (filter positive? (list 1 -2 6 7 0))
'(1 6 7)
```

The test function can be specified:

```
> (filter 
    (lambda(x) (> x 2))    ; function to test each element
    '(1 2 3 4 5))          ; full input list to be filtered
```

Output:

```
'(3 4 5)                   ; output list of elements greater than 2
```

### Length 7

println : one of most commonly used function. Prints out the sent string with a newline character at end:

```
(println "String to be printed")
```

(Note: examples are from various sources on the net).

Answer (score 8):

### [Copy](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/copy)

Copy is my new esolang. The only branching operations are skipping a instruction and code removing and copying, and the only arithmetic operations addition and negation.

#### Length 6

```
skip 0
```

`skip` skip the next instruction if its argument is not 0. So here, it's essentially a no-op.

#### Length 7

```
add a 5
```

Add 5 to the variable `a`. Since `a` is undefined, it set it to 5.

#### Length 8

```
add a -8
```

Add `-8` to the variable `a`. This is to demonstrate than signed numbers are allowed as command arguments.

Comment: Good luck getting enough to make a working program. :P

Comment: Where's 1 to 5? You don't have to make full programs, you know - something like `skip` is acceptable.

Answer (score 8):

## [Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme)

With all the scheme dialects out there, I suppose it was inevitable that a Pyramid Scheme should arise. Created in early 2017 by our very own [Conor O'Brien](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/conor-obrien), this 2D esolang does in fact read very much like Scheme!

#### Length 1

```
^
```

This little guy is the start of everything. The tip of a pyramid. Without the caret, there can be no Pyramid Scheme. On its own, though, it's not a valid program; you've gotta rest the pyramidion on something...

#### Length 3

```
^
-
```

There it is. A full pyramid, complete with base and capstone. This 3-byter is the shortest program that will not error; it prints `0` followed by a newline and terminates gracefully. What it's really doing is accessing the default value of the variable-without-a-name; more on variables later, once we have larger pyramids.

#### Length 4

```
​
^
-
```

Exactly as before, but now with a leading blank line! This program does nothing; it is the shortest possible program of the sort. Execution in Pyramid Scheme always begins on the first line. Each pyramidion on that first line is evaluated, and then the results are printed with linefeeds between if nothing has yet been printed. As the first line here is blank, nothing gets evaluated or printed.

#### Length 5

```
^^
--
```

On the other end, here's a program with more than one pyramid at the top. The one on the left will be evaluated first (yielding 0, as in the length-3), followed by that on the right. The results are collected in a list during execution; once all evaluation is complete, since nothing has yet been printed, the results are dumped to stdout:

```
0
0
​
```

Answer (score 8):

## [1+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/1%2B)

I know the restriction is relaxed now but I "wanted" to follow the old rules, because 1. I'm lazy 2. I want people to care about it

And yes I do have more (currently hidden from the rest of the wrodl) snippets I'll post them if you upvote

#### Factoid

1+ is a fun deque-based language (although it's often referred to as a stack-based language). `1` is the only literal and, furthermore, we only have `+` and `*` but not `-` or `/`, which makes some 1+ programs fairly hard to write. (Or probably I'm just not particularly clever whatever) It's still, however, easier to use than most Turing tarpits.

#### 1 byte

```
1
```

The only literal in 1+. Almost no program can be built without it.

#### 2 bytes

```
1+
```

Yay, language name! It increments the top of the stack. This is where the name of the 1+ chatroom, "increment", come from. It's non-trivial to decrement the top of the stack, however.

#### 3 bytes

```
"<*
```

Damn community wiki, I don't even know when I was upvoted... until now.

This snippet features the `<` operator. It's the only comparison operator in 1+, and returns the boolean value `a <= b` (where `b` is the stack top and `a` is the number behind it). Also, `"` duplicates the top of the stack and `*` multiplies the top two numbers.

This snippet pops the stack if the stack have at least 2 numbers. (It is impossible to get back to an empty stack without outputting.) Because `a <= a` is always true it replaces the stack top with `1`. Then the multiply operator get rid of that 1 since `a * 1 = a`.

#### 4 bytes

```
1+1<
```

Inverts the top of stack. (That is, if the stack top is 0 replace it with 1, otherwise replace it with 0.) This actually turned out to be quite useful in some places, for example dealing with 1+ control flow.

It works by computing `a + 1 <= 1` and not `a <= 0` since pushing a zero is 5 bytes `11+1<`.

#### 5 bytes

```
(|())
```

Infinite recursion. This is a function definition, but functions are executed once when they are declared in 1+ (very golfing-friendly).

The function declaration syntax in 1+ is `(name|code)` and it is called with `(name)`. Here the name of the function is empty and it calls itself repeatedly.

#### 7 bytes

```
(|"<##)
```

I don't have anything for 6 bytes, so here you go. This is a pop function that works anywhere (unless the stack is empty, of course). It's here to showcase the `#` instruction (The only other place I remember using this function is the input template) which is the only type of control flow. It pops a number n, and jumps to the instruction after the nth `#`. (It is 0-indexed, which is sometimes really annoying when golfing but sometimes, [not so much.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208961/87986))

Functions creates "seperate lines of execution" according to original specs - this confuses lots of readers! Interpreter-wise, when executing a function, the interpreter calls itself. This means all `#` outside the function are ignored and the indexing starts from 0 again. (And all `#` inside the functions are ignored in the main line, that's what was meant by seperate lines of execution.)

This snippet creates a function with an empty name (because functions are executed once when they are declared, there are no need to call it). New function definitions overrides old definitions, so it will always work.

`"<` replaces the top number with 1, the original value doesn't matter, much like the 3 byte snippet. The following `#` pops a number, in this case it is 1, and jumps to the second `#` (don't forget it's 0-indexed!) so the 1 is gone. Then we reached the end of the function.

Comment: Explain downvote.

Comment: Lyxal probably accidentally downvoted...

Comment: @petStorm Accidentally X Intentionally V

Comment: Just a note: I ran out of ideas.

Answer (score 8):

## [zsh](https://www.zsh.org)

### 1 byte

```
a
```

`a` is not (normally) a defined command in `zsh`, so why is it useful? Because it generates an error message (`zsh: command not found: a`). Errors are a key part of `zsh` golfing, because it (and other languages in the Bourne shell family) is unique among practical programming languages in their error handling - almost all errors are ignored by default, which is great for golfing. Also, since errors are so easily to generate, they are also essentially the best way to implement conditionals:

### 2 bytes

```
&&
```

The `&&` operator chains two commands together, but only runs the second if the first succeeds. There is also `||`, which does the opposite. They are pretty much the shortest way to implement conditional expressions, because if you can make your command generate an error in some circumstances, then you can use `&&` instead of a bulky `if` statement.

### 3 bytes

```
>$1
```

This is probably one of the most used trigraphs in my `zsh` answers, but what does it do?

Well, the parts in isolation are `$1` is the first command-line argument, and `>` redirects a command to a file. But there is no command? Ah, but when no command is provided, `zsh` uses the value of the `NULLCMD` environment variable, or `cat` by default. Therefore, it `cat`s all of `stdin` to a file named the first command-line argument. `stdin` is generally not the optimal input method, and therefore I don't use it often, so it doesn't generally matter what goes into the file, but it matters that the file is created.<sup>[1]</sup>

Why does it matter that we create a file? Because the shortest way to do string pattern-matching in `zsh` is with so-called "globbing". A glob pattern-matches to a file. I've given an overview of globbing syntax [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219491), but it's generally the easiest and shortest way to check if two strings are equal, or check for substrings or match all sorts of patterns (especially with the `--extendedglob` option). You can even create patterns dynamically, like I used in my [*Is it a lobster number?* answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217969).

<sub>[1] If `stdin` is really needed, you can use `:>$1` which pipes a no-op command, or enable the `--shnullcmd` option which changes that `cat` default to a no-op</sub>

### 4 bytes

```
echo
```

The `echo` builtin prints a string, like `echo hello`. Pretty simple, right? But we can actually do 2 bytes better, with the `<<<` syntax:

```
<<<hello
```

This is called "here-string" redirection, and it's equivalent to doing `echo hello | command`. Like before, there is no command, however, so it's passed to `cat` (see `NULLCMD` above) and hence to `stdout`.

The `<<<` syntax has some limitations, like:

- it only expects a single word, so some expansion/word splitting techniques don't work
- the expression on the right is evaluated in a subshell, so assigning variables there won't take effect outside the command
- it's not a true command, so it can't be aliased and can't always be used in some complex statements
- if you want to print only a newline, a bare `echo` is one byte shorter than `<<<""`

...but it can be chained without command separators, like `<<<a<<<b`, because multiple redirections are going to `cat` (thanks to multIOs). This is particurlarly useful in `eval` "loops" (see **7 bytes**)

### 5 bytes

```
set -y
```

Unlike most shells, zsh does not perform field splitting by default, so variable expansions almost never need to be quoted. The `-y` option re-enables such splitting, which is useful in some circumstances.

`zsh` in fact has [a plethora of command-line options](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/qjhDQVc3IzWn4P9/AA), most of which can also be set dynamically with `set`, `setopt`, or `unsetopt`; some more interesting options include:

- `-e`: errors are no longer ignored, and the shell exits immediately if one happens. If you can generate errors in some circumstances, this can act like a logical AND over the program which is useful for [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem)s
- `-n`: [disables all command execution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218012). Who knows why...
- `--extendedglob`: enables a whole load of extra syntax goodies for globbing
- `-F`: globbing is disabled. This is useful if you don't need to do any pattern matching but want to include unquoted special characters like `*`. Particularly useful in [ascii-art](/questions/tagged/ascii-art)
- `--forcefloat`: changes division in arithemtic expansions to always produce a `float`, even if both operands are integers
- `--cprecedences`: changes operator precedence of bitwise operators in arithmetic expansions. By default they are tighter-binding than even exponentiation, and this makes them exactly as they are in C[2]

You can find the full documentation for all of these in `man zshoptions`.

<sub>[2] although this still isn't the most sensible, as comparison operators are tighter than bitwise AND/XOR/OR<sub>, in what may go down in history as Dennis Ritchie's greatest mistake</sub></sub>

### 6 bytes

```
hash -d
```

While not so useful in [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), but this provides a mechanism very handy for interactive command-prompt use of `zsh`. You may know that `~` refers to the home directory; well now you can define more directory aliases of the form `~a`. For example, `hash -d a=/usr/local` means that `echo ~a/bin/cat` will print `/usr/local/bin/cat`.

It [might be useful](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219712) in [restricted-source](/questions/tagged/restricted-source), but I haven't actually found a use for it yet outside my dotfiles.

### 7 bytes

```
{1..$1}
```

`{1..$1}` constructs a range from `1` to the input, and expands them as separate words. This alone is not too interesting, but if you put some more string around it, like `x{1..$1}y`, then it can create a range with the string, like `x1y x2y x3y ...`. If you replace `x` and `y` with partial snippets of `zsh` code, and then pass them to the `eval` builtin (which evaluates strings as `zsh` code), you can construct ugly-looking loops, which are often shorter than using `for`.

### 8 bytes

```
${a/w/}
```

The `${...}` construct introduces parameter expansion. In the above example we are doing a text replacement on variable `$a`, and removing any `w` characters from its contents. Zsh has a pretty reasonable regex engine. Parameter expansion also does tricky things with arrays and expansion flags. [Example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233823)

### 9 bytes

```
alias A=B
```

`alias` defines token aliases (in the sense of C pre-processor macros), so in the example above, `A` will be replaced with `B` in parsing. If you're using a particular construct often, this can shorten it. For example, to output a lot of stuff, you can do[4]:

```
alias A=repeat\ 1000000
alias B='A A A A'
alias C='B B B B'
C C C C echo hi
```

With a little syntactic trickery, you can even alias operators:

```
alias X='&&'
(true)X echo hi
# => hi
(false)X echo hi
# no output
```

<sub>[3] Actually, for normal commands alone, it's shorter to define a function: `A()command $@;`</sub>
<sub>[4] This is by far non-optimal for the most finite output, but what ever</sub>

### 10 bytes

```
emulate sh
```

zsh has a built-in command to make its behaviour much more closely mirror the POSIX shell standard (and it can also emulate `csh` and `ksh`). I don't think it will ever have a use in [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), except maybe [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) or [polyglot](/questions/tagged/polyglot), but it's another reason that `zsh` should be the only shell installed on your system.

### Factoid

Who needs `awk`, `sed`, or half of the other core unix utils when you can write simple Zsh code like the following from the [Zsh User Guide](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide05.html)?

> *This chapter will appeal above all to people who are excited by the fact that 
> `print ${array[(r)${(l.${#${(O@)array//?/X}[1]}..?.)}]` 
> prints out the longest element of the array `$array` [...] This is for advanced students only (nutcases, if you ask me).*

Comment: Instead of `hash -d` I use [`zoxide`](https://github.com/ajeetdsouza/zoxide) (which is kinda like `autojump` or `zsh-z`). It allows you to navigate directories with a single `z <dir>` where `dir` is a recent directory, or partial match of its name.

Answer (score 7):

## Stylus

Considering CSS is in here, I might as well add this in.

Stylus is a language which is compiled in to CSS3. It's easy to use and adds many features in to the language, like nesting, variables, functions, maths, and relaxed punctuation requirements.

### Length 1

```
=
```

Unlike other CSS pre-processor syntaxes, Stylus allows a variable to be named by any Unicode character that isn't a whitespace, number, or used symbol, without using the `$` symbol to denote variables. CSS does not have any concept of a variable.

### Length 2

```
p
    a
```

Nesting allows you to stop repeating the names of the elements, and looks much prettier and easier for a person to read.

Answer (score 7):

## [Poslin](https://bitbucket.org/thomas_bartscher/poslin/downloads)

### Factoid

Poslin is a concatenative language with strict postfix notation and a metacircular interpreter.

It is similar to the language described in [EWD28](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD00xx/EWD28.html) in principle but is not inspired by it.

Unlike the language described in the linked paper, the immediateness of a symbol is definable in code, allowing the programmer to define almost arbitrary new syntax.
Things like the symbol table and lexical environments exist as first class objects.

Every token in Poslin is surrounded by whitespace.

### Length 1 snippet

```
!
```

This is actually not a working program. Executing it in a fresh session gives a `stack-bottom-error`. This operation is immediate and executes the operation on top of the current stack. Without it, nothing would ever happen.

### Length 2 snippet

```
&+
```

This also isn't a working program. `&` is an immediate operation to compile something into a [*thread*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_code). `&+` also is an immediate operation, but after compiling it executes the operation stored at a place accessible via `HOOK compilation-hook slot-sub-get`.

This way users can define their own optimization passes.

### Length 3 snippet

```
[ ]
```

This creates an empty stack. `[]` also creates an empty stack ad does so much more efficiently. That's because Poslin works with something which is called the *path*. The path is a stack of *environments*, where environments are kind of like prototyped objects, that is, they are mappings (from symbols to bindings) which can have parent-environments. When some object is found by the reader which is not an immediate symbol, it is put onto a stack which is saved in a *binding* (besides the path, the return stack and arguably streams the only mutable data structures in poslin) which is found under the symbol `STACK` in the environment on top of the path.

`[` puts a new environment onto the path which contains a fresh binding containing an empty stack for it's `STACK`. `]` pops the topmost environment off the path and then extracts the stack saved in the binding in its `STACK` slot.

`[]` just constantly returns an empty stack.

`[]`, `[` and `]` are all immediate.

### Length 4 snippet

```
'& &
```

There is no single operation in poslin which defines a new operation. Well, actually there are several, but they're all defined in the standard library, which is written in a subset of poslin called "poslin0".

`&` has the purpose of transforming a given object into a thread.

For threads it's just an identity operation.

Symbols are looked up in an environment saved in a binding in the `OP` slot of the environment on top of the path.

Stacks are converted by turning everything but threads into constant functions returning that object and then concatenating together the resulting objects into one thread. At least, that's roughly how it works. This means, of course, that any operation which should be called inside a thread created this way needs to be turned into a thread via `&` before the calling thread is constructed.

Every other object is turned into a constant thread returning that exact object.

`'&` is special syntax: The leading `'` tells the reader that this is a quotation, that is, everything after the `'` is interpreted as a symbol (including any other `'`s) and then just put onto the current stack without checking for immediateness.

So the given snippet returns the thread of our poslin compiler. It is used in the operation `]o`, which defines a new operation. With the knowledge given up to this point, you might be able to figure out how defining an operation works conceptually, even if you are missing some important operations.

### Length 5 snippet

```
$:
":
```

This is the string you'd normally see as `"\""` in most other languages, that is, the string containing exactly the double-quote character.

The character `$` starts a *delimited string*. A delimited string has a delimiter, which is given between the `$` and the next newline. The string contains all characters between that newline and the next occurence of the delimiter **followed by some kind of whitespace**.

If the delimiter occurs and is not followed by whitespace, it is a part of the string and does not function as delimiter. Remember: Every token in Poslin is surrounded by whitespace.

So, the given string could also be written as

```
$"
""
```

or even `"""`, as Poslin recognizes the usual syntax for strings, too. It does not recognize any escape sequences.

### Length 6 snippet

```
+ call
```

This is almost equivalent to `+ &`. The important difference is that `+ &` returns the thread of `+` while `+ call` returns a thread which reads the binding which holds the definition of `+` and then calls the content of that binding. So, if you expect that the definition of `+` might change and you need to call the new definition instead of the old one, use `+ call`.

This is necessary for defining recursive operations. There is no way to insert a thread into itself, so the binding which is later intended to contain the thread is inserted instead via `call` and after the thread is constructed it is written into that binding.

### Length 7 snippet

```
. ? ! !
```

`?` consumes the top three elements off the stack. The third from the top needs to be a boolean value. If it is true, the second from top is put back onto the stack, if it is false the first from top is put back onto the stack.

`.` is simply the no-op.

So this is an immediate `when`. Imagine the following stack:

```
[ 2 TRUE P{negation} ]
```

This proceeds as follows with the above sequence:

```
[ 2 TRUE P{negation} . ]
[ 2 TRUE P{negation} . ? ]
[ 2 P{negation} ]
[ -2 ]
```

Whereas if the stack is

```
[ 2 FALSE P{negation} ]
```

It proceeds thus:

```
[ 2 FALSE P{negation} . ]
[ 2 FALSE P{negation} . ? ]
[ 2 . ]
[ 2 ]
```

Answer (score 7):

## [JacobFck](http://github.com/JacobMisirian/JacobFck)

JacobFck is a stack based esoteric language written in C#. It is capable of all basic operations as well as some more common operations. It is a slight mix of BrainFuck *like* syntax and Forth. The link above links to the JacobFck GitHub.

#### Length 1

`>`

This is one of the simplest instructions. It writes to the screen whatever is at the top of the stack.

#### Length 2

`^5`

The ^ instruction tells the interpreter that we are going to be pushing data (either number or register value) onto the stack. In this case, the number 5.

#### Length 3

`"s"`

Strings (encased in "") are automatically pushed to the top of the stack, and \n \t \r are all supported escape codes.

#### Length 4

`^2<+`

This code would push 2 to the stack with the ^ instruction, push user input to the stack with the < instruction, and add the two together by popping them off the stack and pushing the result to the top.

### Length 5

`:a<_a`

This code is an example of an infinite loop. `:a` declared the label a. < is the instruction to prompt the user for input. `_a` goes to the label a.

Answer (score 7):

## [Carrot](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/)

## 4-byte code

```
0^*2
```

(Prints `000`)

I have chosen to use this snippet because of its weirdness. So the first bit of the code says that the stack is `0`. Then the `*` is string multiplication. It multiplies `"0"` 2 times. One would expect the output to be `00`, but no! `000` is outputted instead. So the stack is repeated `2+1=3` times, which gives `000`. This trick is useful for golfing when  you want to output the stack 10 times. Instead of going `(stack)^*10`, you will do `(stack)^*9` because it saves **one** byte!

## 3-byte code

```
$^P
```

The `$` is the alternative to `#` for taking input. In the future I hope to distinguish these two similar functions... Coming back to the topic, we see the caret `^` for the first time. This is to differentiate the stack from the commands. Then comes the `P`. This checks if the stack is a prime or not(works for the number 1). This primality checking works on the stack both as a *string* or as a number. This "special power" of `P` can make it more useful for code-golfing.

## 2-byte code

```
#A
```

Outputs *input*A. If the input is `C`, then the output would be `CA`

This piece of code shows two interesting properties of Carrot:

1. One is that the string "A" does not need to be enclosed in quotes in the stack.
2. The other one is that the plus "+" sign for concatenation is not required in the stack. The two strings, the input and the "A", get joined together automatically.

## 1-byte code

```
#
```

This is a simple program that prints the output as it is. The `#` can be used in the commands or the stack section of the program. The caret `^` is not required because we do not wish to use commands.

Factoid: Carrot is a language made by me, Kritixi Lithos, based on this [carrot meme](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7330/41805) of PPCG. Every Carrot program as of version ^2 must have a `^` in it. The structure of every program is as follows: `stack^commands`.

Comment: whaaat no carrot required? XD

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Carets are not required from Version ^3 and forth if we want to use no commands.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ There! The carrot is back again in the third byte!

Answer (score 7):

## [Simplex](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Simplex/)

Version is the latest, unless otherwise specified; interpreter is currently down; docs a little unupdated as of now.

---

### 6-vote

```
1(D)10
1      ~~ sets current byte to 1
 ( )10 ~~ repeat inner 100 times
  D    ~~ double current byte
       ~~ implicitly output byte
```

This outputs `2^10` *in its exact form*. Simplex has something I liked to call “Infinite Capacity Numerics®”. It can be a bit slow sometimes, but is/will be highly precise.

### 5-vote

```
"hi"g
```

Writes a string `hi` to the strip and outputs it.

### 4-vote

```
eRPE
```

Outputs *e<sup>π</sup>* ≈ 23.1406926328. `e` is Euler's number, `R` goes right in the strip, `P` is π, and `E` is exponentiation. Output is implicit.

### 3-vote

```
i¢I
```

A little code that takes numeric input, terminates if input = zero, otherwise increments the byte. Implicitly outputs the result. (It's also French! (ish): *ici => here*)

### 2-vote

```
MO
```

Shortest way to create a bounds error; `M` decrements the byte and `O` goes to the `current byte`th position in the source code…maybe I *should* include negative source codes…nah, who'd go for it?

### 1-vote

```
5
```

Not very interesting, but writes 5 to the current strip's first cell. (Also implicitly outputs 5.)

### 0-vote

Simplex is a golfing language which functions similar to BrainF***, made by me. It is very much a work in progress, but has about 60 standard commands. It is composed of a singular field, which holds a bottom-closed, top-open, infinite amount of strips, each of which contains a right-open, left-closed, infinite amount of cells and a pointer. The field can be visualized as thus:

```
5: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... ]
    ^
4: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... ]
    ^
3: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... ]
    ^
2: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... ]
    ^
1: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... ]
    ^
0: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... ]
    ^
```

Each pointer moves independent of other pointers. Typically, only one or two strips are utilized in a single program.

Comment: `¢` is two bytes

Comment: @SuperJedi224 [no, it isn't.](http://bytesizematters.com/)

Comment: @SuperJedi224 And even if it was, this challenge is graded on _characters_, not bytes.

Comment: in UTF-8, it is. I suppose you're right that it doesn't matter here though.

Answer (score 7):

## [GoLScript](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/GoLScript/)

[Interpreter](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/GoLScript/interpreter.html).

### 5-vote

```
HAAZW
```

This is another simple program.

#### Generation 0

`H` pushes `7`, `A` pushes `0`. `Z` is a fun command that pops `Y`, `X` and pushes the character at `FIELD[Y][X]`, or (X,Y). In this case, the character at (0,0) is `H`, and so it's char code is pushed. `W` outputs this as a character.

The two outer-most cells die.

#### Generation 1

We are left with `AAZ`, another call to `Z`, pushing `h`'s char code to the stack (as the former `H` is now dead and thus lowercase). However, since the `W` died, it can no longer function, and thus, this phase ends.

Once again, the two outermost cells die.

#### Generation 2

Now, only `A` is left, which carries out its duty in pushing a `0`, and then dies. The program is effectively stopped.

### 4-vote

```
Bp
P
```

(newline counts as a character, iirc.) This does something rather simple:

1. The program is first `BpP`. This pushes `1` (`B`), pops a value (`1`) and assumes it `p => P`, and does that again, popping a zero from the bottom of the stack `P => p`.

   1. Checking, only the new `P` survives, as it popped a value and lived. The rest of the characters died.
2. After, only the `P` remains; it pops an empty value (`0`) and dies.

### 3-vote

```
JXJ
```

First multi-step program! Here's what happens:

#### Generation 0

The code is evaluated: `J` pushes `9` to the stack, `X` pops a number and prints it, and `J` again pushes `9` ot the stack.

The cells' live-states are updated. Both `J`s die, having only 1 neighbour. The `X` lives, as it has 2 neighbours.

#### Generation 1

All that remains is the `X`. This prints the remaining `9` off the stack.

The `X` dies, and the program terminates.

#### Final output

```
99
```

Hey, it's a start…

### 2-vote

```
@V
```

The shortest (?) still life in GoLScript. `@` negates the top of the stack (effectively pushing `true`) and `V` reads the top of the stack, and dies if the value is falsey. Replacing `@` with any of `B-J` would also produce a still life.

### 1-vote

```
X
```

Any 1-length program is valid. This one takes a zero of the stack (there is an infinite amount of zeroes atop the stack) and outputs it as a number.

### 0-vote (factoid)

GoLScript simulates Conway's Game of Life! Yay! [Interpreter](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/GoLScript/interpreter.html). You'll have to copy-paste the codes, and output is the bottom-most code block.

---

#### Language information

- GoLScript is stack-based.
- GoLScript has no native string quoting!

Comment: When will we run out of names beginning with `Gol...`? Gol><>, Golfscript, GoLScript, Golang (okay, not very golfy, but you get my point) :P

Comment: @cat upvote it if you like it ;) it's "Game of Life"...

Comment: I think you meant `Game of Code Golf`, since Code Golf is life...

Comment: @cat GOCG doesn't have as nice of a ring to it ^_^

Comment: Add permalinks to the Interpreter

Comment: @Cyoce they don't have perms links

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ exactly. Make them have permalinks

Answer (score 7):

## [Wierd](http://catseye.tc/node/Wierd)

**Factoid**

Unlike other languages where the symbols in a program determine which instructions are executed, in Wierd, it is the bends in the chain of arbitrary symbols that determine which instructions are executed.

Chris Pressey created the angle-to-instruction mapping, and christened the entire mess "Wierd"--a cross between the words "weird" (which the language seemed to be) and "wired" (which would describe the appearance of programs written in the language)

You can try it online at http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia)

**Length 1 Snippet**

```
!
```

The actual character used doesn't matter - it can be any non whitespace character.
This program doesn't do anything because there are no bends in the chain of characters - but there is a chain so at least it is a valid program.

**Length 2 Snippet**

```
++
```

Now we are going somewhere - we have a chain of characters.  Still no bends so you wouldn't expect it to do anything but unintuitively this program does actually do something.

The current location starts in the top left corner facing "diagonally down and right".  The current location always moves with inertia - it will move in the direction it is already moving until it can no longer do that and then will move in a direction closest to the current direction.

So the current location has to change 45 degrees so that it can continue to the right and that counts as a 45 degree bend so we push 1 onto the stack - exactly the same outcome as the Length 5 Snippet.

**Length 3 Snippet**

```
+
+
```

Same as the Length 2 Snippet this program does actually do something because the current location starts in the top left corner facing "diagonally down and right" and the current location has to change 315 degrees so that it can continue to the right and that counts as a 315 degree bend which will subtract the two items on the top of the stack.  But there is nothing on the stack so the bend is a no-op and the program does nothing.

**Length 4 Snippet**

```
+
 +
```

The current location starts in the top left corner facing "diagonally down and right" so there are no bends in this chain of characters and so this program doesn't do anything.

**Length 4 Snippet**

```
+
++
```

Finally a program with a bend! But it doesn't do anything useful :(

The current location starts in the top left corner facing "diagonally down and right".  The current location always moves with inertia - it will move in the direction it is already moving until it can no longer do that and then will move in a direction closest to the current direction.

So the current location moves "diagonally down and right" and arrives at the next bend.  It is a 225 degree bend so if the stack were to contain a zero it would push one character of standard input onto the stack and if it were a nonzero value then a value from the stack would be written to standard output.  But there is nothing on the stack so the bend is a no-op.

Now the current location moves around the bend without doing anything, the current direction is towards the left and we are at another bend.  This one is a 270 degree bend so if the stack were to contain a nonzero value the current direction would reverse.  But there is nothing on the stack so the bend is a no-op.

Now the current location moves around the bend without doing anything, the current direction is up and we are at another bend.  It is a 270 degree bend so if the stack were to contain a nonzero value the current direction would reverse.  But there is nothing on the stack so the bend is a no-op.

Now the current location moves around the bend without doing anything, and we are in an infinite loop.

**Length 5 Snippet**

```
+
 ++
```

Finally a program that does something!

The current location starts in the top left corner facing "diagonally down and right" so the current location moves "diagonally down and right" and arrives at the next bend.  It is a 45 degree bend so we push 1 onto the stack.

There are only four ways to get values onto the stack:

- Push a 1
- Subtract two values already on the stack
- Use a value on the stack to decide to read from standard input
- Use corordinates on the stack to read a value embedded in the program

So the only way to get a value onto an empty stack is to push a 1.

Answer (score 7):

## [Reng](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/cxuf2e75/)

### 5-vote

```
1¶:+!
```

This uses an intersting feature: default stack pop override! `¶` pops `n` and sets `n` to the default value when popping from an empty stack. (This is `0` by default.) What this code does is initially lay down a `1`, sets that as a default pop, `:` duplicates value (getting default pop) and adds it with the default pop, leaving twice the default pop on the stack. `!` skips the `1` instruction, and `¶` sets the default pop to twice what it was.

### 4-vote

```
is~o
```

This is a cat program. It takes input (`i`), `s` jumps if the byte != -1, and `o` outputs. When reading EOF for input, `-1` is put on the stack, and the program terminates.

### 3-vote

```
9#q
```

This stores the number `9` in the variable `q`.

### 2-vote

```
{}
```

Reng has codeblocks! This pushes an empty codeblock to the stack. Forever.

### 1-vote

```
~
```

This ends the program.

### 0-vote

Reng is like ><>, but with some more functionality. Not made for golfing, as you may come to see... ;)

Answer (score 7):

## [Quetzalcoatl](https://bitbucket.org/max1234/quetzalcoatl)

#### 6 snippet:

`{c.I?}`.

Makes a block with Code Snippet 4.

#### 5 snippet:

`{c.I}`

Makes a code block, containing the code `c.I`. On snippet `8`, we will use this.

#### 4 snippet:

`c.I?`

Same as before, but also does power. Result is xth root of x.

#### 3 snippet:

`c.I`

Outputs `(input, 1/input)` because `I` in `1/`.

#### 2 snippet:

`c` (or any token) + `-q` compiler flag

<s>Proper</s> quine. `-q` outputs source instead of running code.

#### 1 snippet:

`1` or  (no code) + `-n` (1 byte).

Like in GolfScript, numbers just push their value. This outputs `1` because Quetzalcoatl implicitly prints the stack. This works for any digit `0-9`. Second snippet outputs `Quetzalcoatl`, because `-n` outputs `Quetzalcoatl`.

#### Interesting fact:

> Quetzalcoatl got its name from the Aztec snake god (I wrote it).

Comment: Is this meant to be a golfing language?

Comment: @Cyoce This is a golfing language.

Answer (score 7):

## [Molecule](https://github.com/lvivtotoro/molecule)

**Factoid**
Molecule is the descendent of Pylongolf2, a descendent of Pylongolf which was based on CJam.

**0 byte snippet:**

This does not do anything as it is empty.

**1 byte snippet:**

```
I
```

`I` read the input.
As Molecule outputs everything in the stack once the program shuts down, this makes a decent cat program.

**2 byte snippet:**

```
()
```

Anything between `(` and `)` is looped until `!` is called.

**3 byte snippet:**

```
Inh
```

Read the input, convert it into a number.
The `h` converts numbers into characters.
So you can get some funky characters by using this.

**4 byte snippet:**

```
`q`n
```

Now here's where you could break the program.
Molecule has a built-in reflections system that allows you to modify the source code at runtime.
`` `q `` Push the source code, `` `n `` sets the source code to itself.
From v5.5, this snippet forces the interpreter to read from the start, creating a loop.

**5 byte snippet:**

```
0(1+~)
```

Have your program count until it reaches Infinity.. then it crashes.
(On my computer takes about 2 minutes to crash :P)

**6 byte snippet:**

```
u10000
```

Print 10000. What is so interesting about this?
It's interesting because putting a simple `10000` will push 1 and 5 zeroes to the stack, while the `u` keyword pushes the entire number after it.

Comment: I can't wait for the 2 byte snippet!

Answer (score 7):

## Desmos

Factoid: The Desmos community has a wealth of programs that use many math equations to make them work.  Take, for example, [this 3D visualizer](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vymzvpqp3k).

#### 1 byte

```
x
```

One of my favorite things about Desmos is that you can write out equations like this without having to put y= before it, as Desmos automatically does it for you.

Comment: Sorry, but I've [already done Desmos](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/showcase-your-language-one-vote-at-a-time/58967#58967) here.

Answer (score 7):

## [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org)

### Description:

Coffeescript is a language that compiles into Javascript. It's much less verbose than JS (and about the same as ES6), which makes it friendlier for [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)ing.

### Factoid:

Coffeescript doesn't require brackets with function calls.

### Length 1 Snippet:

```
=
```

The `=` sign means a lot of things in Coffeescript - it can assign both functions and variables in one fell swoop, much like Javascript.

### Length 2 Snippet:

```
**
```

This is the power sign, which is used like this: `a**b`. It replaces JS's `Math.pow(a,b)`, which saves 11 bytes.

### Length 3 Snippet:

```
(n)
```

This is an argument in CoffeeScript, and is used like so:

```
{function name} = (arg1, arg2...) ->
```

(This is basically the same as JS, but I just wanted to show off functions - because they're so different).

### Length 4 Snippet:

```
0..5
```

For-loops are different in CoffeeScript. This snippet, when put into this context:

```
for a in[0..5]
```

Is the same as JavaScript's

```
for (a=0, a<5, a++)
```

and Python's

```
for a in range(5)
```

As you can see, this snippet shows the byte-saving powers of CS.

### Length 5 Snippet:

```
n=->1
```

Yay, a full function!

This snippet creates a function, `n`, with no arguments, which outputs 1.

### Length 6 Snippet:

```
if n<1
```

This is an `if` statement, in CS. Notice the lack of a colon, or curly brackets (yes, no curly brackets!). This compares `n`, and checks if it's less than 1.

Simple enough.

### Length 7 Snippet:

```
class A
```

This is a class declaration in CoffeeScript. Despite there being no support for classes in JavaScript, there's classes in CS - and they work exactly the way you expect them to.

Comment: That `=` declaring functions sounds bad to me. I would say, it is another case when a value is assigned to a variable, just the value is not number or string, but an anonymous function.

Comment: `Math.power` don't exists; the correct function is `Math.pow`

Answer (score 7):

## [Logicode](http://github.com/LogicodeLang/Logicode)

### Factoid:

Logicode has a very limited amount of built-ins (7 built-ins, of which 6 are single-char), which makes it pretty difficult to program anything meaningful in.

Also, it's built on logic gates, as the name suggests, and that's it - which makes it doubly hard to code stuff in.

You can try it online [here](http://logicode.tryitonline.net).

### Length 1 Snippet:

```
+
```

The `+` is not addition, as that can be achieved easily. It's concatenation between two "numbers" (which are binary): So, something like `11+1` is not `100`, as with regular binary addition, but `111`.

### Length 2 Snippet:

```
->
```

`->` is used in two main things: circuits (which are Logicode's version of functions) and conditionals (`if` statements). It is used to separate the executed code from the arguments (in the case of circuits) or the condition (in the case of conditionals).

### Length 3 Snippet:

```
out
```

This is a declarer, kinda like `var` in Javascript to declare a new variable. Logicode has a declarer for anything: `out` for output, `var` for variables, `circ` for circuits (which are basically functions in Logicode), `cond` for conditionals.

### Length 4 Snippet:

```
!100
```

The `!` is a logical NOT, which is operated on every digit of the binary string that follows. In this case, the snippet evaluates to `011`.

### Length 5 Snippet:

```
1&1&1
```

In Logicode, you're allowed to stack multiple two-arg (dyadic) operators together, as seen here. The `&` is a logical AND, and the snippet evaluates to `1`.

### Length 6 Snippet:

```
@11011
```

Yay, ASCII support! Because the default "type" of Logicode is binary strings, the `@` converts binary to ASCII codes (mod 256). In this case, the character generated is `ESC` (ASCII character code 27).

### Length 7 Snippet:

```
1000<<<
```

This program takes the tail of `1000` three times. A tail is essentially every character but the first, so repeating this three times gives us:

```
1000 -> 000 -> 00 -> 0
```

So this evaluates to 0.

Answer (score 7):

## [MiniStringFuck](//esolangs.org/wiki/MiniStringFuck)

MSF- is a way to compress the unique characters of any 0-255 ASCII string to just two characters; and it does pretty well! Although code might just be long.

**Length 1 snippet**

```
.
```

Outputs `0x00`.

**Length 2 snippet**

```
+.
```

Outputs `0x01`. This does not only demonstrate the `.` (output), but also the `+` (accumulator). `+` essentially changes the accumulator's value (`acc`) to `(acc + 1) % 256`.

**Length 3 snippet**

```
,+.
```

It does not really output the next character; it's the same as above, because non-`+.` characters are ignored.

**Length 4 snippet**

```
+.+.
```

Yay multiple chars!! This outputs `\1\2` (escaped chars).

**Length 5 snippet**

```
+.+..
```

This prints `\1\2\2`. Yes, we need *too much* upvotes yet to get to a reasonable program.

**Length 6 snippet**

```
+.+.+.
```

Prints `\1\2\3`. Finally something that looks a little bit more interesting than just some random sequence of unprintables.

Comment: A language with just two commands? Isn't this basically similar to the `0`s and `1`s of Binary? ;p Ah well, +1, looking forward to see what it got in store for us.

Comment: To downvoters: Please do not downvote just because the language isn't awesome. It still has to be showcased.

Answer (score 7):

## [hansl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gretl/files/manual/hansl-primer.pdf)

**hansl** is a programming language that is used in the statistical software project [gretl](http://gretl.sourceforge.net/) since 2001. It resembles a mixture of R, Stata, and C. It operates with datasets, time series, vectors, matrices, and functions. Just as in R, there are dozens of user-written packages for econometrics and data analysis. It is a matrix-oriented interpreted language that is Turing-complete (!). Its fortes are econometric estimation and numerical maximisation, and it can be integrated with R, Ox, Octave, Stata, Python, Julia, and gnuplot.

#### Length 1 snippet

```
~
```

You know how difficult it can be to build matrices from vectors? One can attain the effect by reading the input row-wise, column-wise, or through assembling the mess into a dataset? In hansl, you do not hassle: just write `~` between the two vectors, and voila, you get them bound <s>in tight leather</s> together vertically: `A~B`. Do you have two matrices you want to assemble? `X~Y`, easy as pie.

#### Length 2 snippet

```
$h
```

This neat accessor returns the series of *estimated conditional heteroskedasticity from the last GARCH model*. Doesn’t it amaze you that esoteric programming languages have abbreviations for everything? Take that, MATL!

#### Length 3 snippet

```
ols
```

This is probably the most frequently used estimation method in all of econometrics. This command estimates a linear regression model describing the relationship between the dependent variable and predictors (like `ols wage 0 age education married`), returns the full model and generates many useful accessors (like `$uhat` for residuals, `$aic` for Akaike information criterion etc.)

**Factoid:** Its name comes from the famous fairy tale “Hansel and Gretel” by the Grimm brothers, with a modern twist (like Flick-r, Tumbl-r, and similar names, but **gret-l** omitted the penultimate vowel long before it became mainstream!).

Answer (score 7):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip)

An imperative golfing language with infix operators, with commands in printable ASCII. While these design decisions mean that Pip will probably never beat Jelly in a golf contest, they also make the language much easier to learn and use.

#### Factoid

To my knowledge, Pip was the first golfing language to have built-in regex support.

The header of each snippet is a [TryItOnline](http://pip.tryitonline.net) link.

#### [Length 1](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=YQ&input=&args=SGVsbG8h)

```
a
```

Pip's default method of getting input is by command-line arguments (hereinafter "cmdline args"). The first five args are assigned to the variables `a` through `e`, and the whole list is assigned to `g`.

Since it is at the end of the program, the expression `a` is auto-printed. So this program outputs the first cmdline arg.

#### [Length 2](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=L3E&input=MjU)

```
/q
```

To get input from stdin, use the `q` special variable. Every time it is referenced, it reads a line of input.

Many operators have both binary and unary versions. This is expected behavior for operators like `-`, and makes good sense for others like `^` split and `J` join. Here we have a somewhat unusual example: unary `/` inverts its argument. Inputting `4` will give `0.25` as output, and vice versa.

This snippet also demonstrates a feature that Pip shares with Perl and PHP: numbers are strings and strings are numbers. Both are represented by a data type called Scalar. Upshot: you don't have to convert `q`'s line of input to a number before doing math with it.

But what happens if you input something that's not a number, like `Hello world`? In a numeric context, it's treated as `0`. Dividing by `0`, like most error conditions, returns the special *nil* value, which produces no output when printed. If you want to see what went wrong, you can use the `-w` flag to enable warnings, in which case Pip will tell you:

```
Inverting zero
```

#### [Length 3](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=Xmc&input=&args=LXA+Nw+NDI+SGVsbG8)

Uses the `-p` flag (+1 byte).

```
^g
```

As mentioned above, `g` is a list of all cmdline ar**g**s. Many operators work itemwise on lists, and `^` (split) is one of them. This code splits the items of `g` into lists of characters.

If you ran this 2-byte code without the flag, it wouldn't be obvious what the program did, because Pip's default way of outputting lists is to concatenate the items together. To demonstrate that the split operation worked, we need to change the output format. About half of Pip's [command-line flags](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip/blob/master/Documentation/Command-line%20flags.md) have to do with list formatting. The `-p` flag applies `RP` (analogous to Python's `repr`) to the list before outputting it, making it easy to see the structure:

```
> python pip.py -pe "^g" 42 Hello
[[4;2];["H";"e";"l";"l";"o"]]
```

Use the TIO link above to play around with the other list flags (`-s`, `-n`, `-l`, `-P`, `-S`) and see how the output changes.

#### [Length 4](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=ekA8aA&input=)

```
z@<h
```

Lowercase letters `h` through `z` are global variables, preinitialized to different values. `z` is the lowercase alphabet; `h` is 100.

The `@<` "left-of" operator returns a slice from the left end of an iterable (scalar, list, or range). It's equivalent to Python `iterable[:index]`--*except* that the Pip version works even when the index is greater than the length of the iterable. In that case it repeats the iterable until it's longer than the index, then takes the slice (like `take` + `cycle` in Haskell). So `z@<h` gives the first 100 characters of the lowercase alphabet:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
```

#### [Length 5](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=Mj4xPjA&input=)

```
2>1>0
```

Comparison operators chain, as in Python. This program returns `1` (true).

Answer (score 7):

## Processing

### Factoid:

Processing is kind of like the nicer brother/cousin of Java with its syntactic sugar, which introduces a lot of golfing opportunities, as well as GUI stuff which is built-in (because Processing is made for designers to get into programming). See the snippets for its golfing power (especially for graphics stuff).

### 18 bytes:

```
size(400,400,P3D);
```

This snippet not only sets the dimensions of the window to `400x400`, but also enables `3D` rendering (in just 18 bytes!).

### 7 bytes:

```
println
```

Yup, it's just `println`, not `System.out.println`. It's as simple as that.

### 3 bytes:

```
str
```

There's a builtin for converting to Strings from other types (e.g. `int`, `float`, `long`, etc.) in Processing!

Comment: You aren't restricted by votes anymore, you know.

Answer (score 7):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax)

Stax is a stack-based golf-oriented language.  That's a pretty crowded space, but stax has a few novel properties.  There's an [online interpreter](https://staxlang.xyz/).

### Two stacks

There are two data stacks, "main" and "input".  The language name is inspired by this.  Normally standard input starts on the input stack, split into lines.  Most operations operate on the main stack.  However, if the main stack is empty, read operations fall back to the input stack instead.

### Types

Falsy values are numeric zeroes and empty arrays.  All other values are truthy.

- **Integer** Aribitrary size
- **Float** Standard double precision
- **Rational** Fractions of integers
- **Block** Reference to unexecuted code for map/filter/etc
- **Array** Heterogeneous lists of any values

### Compressed string literals

Stax has a variant of string literals suitable for compressing English-like text with no special characters.  It is compressed using Huffman codes.  It uses a different set of Huffman codes for every pair of preceding characters.  The character weights were derived from a large corpus of English-like text.  `"Hello, World!"` could be written as  `` `jaH1"jS3!` ``.  The language comes with a compression utility.

### Crammed integer arrays

Similarly to compressed string literals, stax also has a special feature for efficiently representing arrays of arbitrary integers.  It uses almost all the printable ascii characters.  It uses the information in each character efficiently to embed how long each integer is, and their values.  This feature is new in Stax 1.0.6.

### Debugger

Stax has a web-based development and execution environment.  It runs entirely client-side with no ajax calls.  It features a step-through debugger that shows the current state, including all registers, stacks, and current instruction.  `` |` `` is a programmatic break instruction.  There is also a C# GUI and CLI for Stax.

### PackedStax

PackedStax is an alternative representation for Stax code.  It is never ambiguous with Stax, since PackedStax always has the leading bit of the first byte set.  That means the same interpreter can be used for both representations with no extra information.  For ease of clipboard use, PackedStax can be represented using a modified CP437 character encoding.  It yields ~18% savings over ASCII.

### Rationals

Stax supports fraction arithmetic.  You can use `u` to turn an integer upside down. So `3u` yields `1/3`.  Fractions are always in reduced terms.  `3u 6*` multiplies 1/3 by 6, but the result will be `2/1`.

### Implicit input eval

Normally the text in the input starts in the input stack.  The stax runtime can parse input into stax data structures.  This is rather convenient for many PPCG posts, where input formats are flexible.  This happens only when certain conditions are met.

- Input contains no newlines
- Parsing input succeeded.  Support types are integers, floats, rationals, strings, and arrays.

For example, this input would be parsed into corresponding values on the input stack.

```
1 2.3 [4/5, "foo"]
```

### Examples

- [Sum of first n naturals](http://stax.tomtheisen.com/#c=F%2B&i=100&a=1)
- [Hello world](http://stax.tomtheisen.com/#c=%C3%A8%C3%AF%E2%94%AC%E2%96%80%E2%86%A8%E2%95%A94G&a=1)
- [Sierpinski triangle](http://stax.tomtheisen.com/#c=.%2F%5C%5D%7Bc%7B2*m%2B%7CC%7D%2C*m&i=5&a=1)
- [Golf the Chinese 9*9 multiple table](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157748/golf-the-chinese-99-multiple-table/157761#157761)

### Snippet: Length 0

An empty program in stax will reduce a fraction.  This is the result of automatically evaluated input, and a built-in rational type.  Rational values are always in reduced terms.  And since there's no explicit output in the program, the top of the stack is implicitly printed.

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=&i=10%2F6&a=1)

#### Snippet: Length 1

A one character stax program can filter out the blank lines from standard input.  `f` is generally used to use a block to filter an array, but when it's the first character of a program, it uses the remainder of the program to filter the input lines.  The rest of the program is blank, so the filter is an identity filter, and blank lines are falsey.

```
f
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=f&i=a%0A%0Abc%0Adef%0A%0Aghij&a=1)

#### Snippet: Length 2

This program iterates over the positive integers from 1 to n and adds them.

```
F+
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=F%2B&i=9&a=1)

#### Snippet: Length 3

This program gets the first `n` letters of the alphabet.  `Va` is the lowercase alphabet.  `(` truncates to the specified input length.

```
Va(
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=Va%28&i=12&a=1)

#### Snippet: Length 4

In 4 bytes, you can use a block to map each character to its ascii code in hexadecimal.  There aren't strings per se in stax, but arrays of character codepoints are treated as strings in many contexts.  `{...m` establishes a block and maps every element in an array using the contents.  `|H` converts a number to hexadecimal.

```
{|Hm
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7B%7CHm&i=foobar&a=1)

There is also a length-4 proper quine in Stax, which is quite different from how most proper quines are constructed.

```
..SS
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=..SS&i=&a=1)

`.` is the leading character for a two-character literal and `..S` is the string literal `".S"`. `S` builds the powerset of the array, excluding the empty set, *i.e.* `[".",".S","S"]`. The result is then implicitly flattened and output.

Answer (score 6):

### Sonic Pi

Code Snippet 4:

```
dice
```

You don't see anything on the output, but if you show it with `puts`, it's a random number. Don't worry if your number is always the same, Sonic Pi uses the same random seed for every run, but that's good because else your songs would sound different every time.

Code Snippet 3:

```
:e1
```

This equals the MIDI-Note 52 and the frequency 164.81377845643496 hz. It must start with a : so Sonic Pi knows it's an integrated constant.
Code Snippet 2:

```
[]
```

Empty list. Sorry, nothing else except comments can be written in two bytes.
Code Snippet 1:

```
#
```

Starts a comment. 
Factoid: Sonic Pi is a sound coding language and is a full valued programming language.

Answer (score 6):

### [ListSharp](https://github.com/timopomer/ListSharp)

**factoid:** ListSharp is an interpeted langauge for list manipulation and web scraping, still in development yet it can already do some neat stuff!

- syntax is heavily word based so a good amount of votes will be needed for functional snipplets

**Length 4 snipplet:**

```
SHOW
```

**[SHOW](https://github.com/timopomer/ListSharp/wiki/SHOW)** is the standard STDOUT of ListSharp and lets you display a variable in complete disregard to its type

Ex:

```
SHOW = "Hello world"
SHOW = {"1","2"} + "3"
SHOW = variable_name
```

Answer (score 6):

### [Golisp](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/golisp)

#### Factoid

Golisp is a very simple programming language, but despite it's name it's not a Lisp dialect.

#### Length 1 snippet

```
0
```

Return `0`, but since this value isn't used this is a no-op.

#### Length 2 snippet

```
""
```

Return a empty string, but since this value isn't used this is a no-op.

#### Length 3 snippet

```
(0)
```

Create a list with 1 element, `0`

#### Length 4 snippet

```
+[1]
```

Call the function `+` with one argument, `1`. The returned value is `1`.

#### Length 5 snippet

```
chr@5
```

Use the shorthand notation `function@argument`. Return the ASCII character `ENQ` (5), but as always, nothing is printed `:/`

#### Length 6 snippet

```
+[3 5]
```

Simply add 3 and 5.

Answer (score 6):

## [Majc](https://github.com/lvivtotoro/majc) (formely hashmap)

**Factoid**
hashmap is not necessarily a golfing language, although it's commands can make it so. (Also it's spelled `hashmap`, not `Hashmap`).
It was renamed in June 11, 2016 to Majc.

**0 byte snippet:**

This does nothing.

**1 byte snippet:**

```
.
```

Clear the stack... now.. there's nothing in the stack.. so...

**2 byte snippet:**

```
id
```

Convert input to a number, this is also the long version of `h`.

**3 byte snippet:**

```
h2^
```

`h` is short for `id`, so we're taking the input as a number and get it's squared.

**4 byte snippet:**

```
{}:a
```

**5 byte snippet:**

```
isrsr
```

Kind of lost ideas here, but `i` takes an input, `sr` reverses it.

I'm not sure if this still works but this created a code block (based on CJam) and assigns it to variable `a`.
Code blocks are like anonymous functions (unless assigned to a variable).

Comment: 2 byte snippet?

Answer (score 6):

## [StackyLogic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84851/run-stackylogic)

### Factoid:

StackyLogic is originially from a codegolf challenge, as seen in the link. It consists of a series of "stacks", however there are no "push" operations.

#### Length 1 Snippet

`<`

This is not a full program at all. This is just the pointer symbol. This symbol denotes where the pointer starts

#### Length 2 Snippet

```
?<
```

This program takes a bit of input, and outputs it. It would be a cat program, if it looped, however Stackylogic possesses no loops.

First, the program will substitute the `?` for either a `1` or `0`, depending on input. Then, it will execute this command. `1` will make the pointer move down one, `0` will make it move up one. Then, upon discovering the empty stack (which are always implicitly exist), it will halt, and output the last executed command, either a `1`, or `0`

#### Length 3 Snippet

```
?1<
```

This program always outputs one, the `?` is never used. This is because, as stated in the previous snippet, `1` will move the pointer down one, and the implicit empty stack will cause the last executed command to be printed. the  `?` isn't used, because the pointer is never directed to it.

#### Length 4 Snippet

```
?
?<
```

Our first program with multiple non-empty stacks.

This program outputs the result of an OR operation on two bits.

How it works:

It first substitutes the `?` under the pointer with a bit from input, and executes it. If it is a `1`, it will go forward, find the empty stack, halt and print `1`.

```
?<
```

If it is a zero, it will go up one, and act like the above code: it will substitute the `?` for a bit, execute it, and then move onto an empty stack and output it.

Note how the code after the first `?` is executed is the same as snippet 2

#### Length 5 snippet

```
1
??<
```

This program, like the last program, outputs the OR of two bits. However, the `?`s are on the same line. if the first bit is one, it will move forward on to an empty stack, output `1`, if it is a 0, it will move back one, on to the one, and then move forward back on to the second `?`, again being identical to the length 2 snippet. This illustrates how multiple programs can have the same effect. You might have noticed that no new language features have been introduced this time. This is because they have all been introduced.

#### Length 6 Snippet

```
1
?<
0
```

This program outputs the not of one bit (the opposite of snippet 2). You might, by now, think that StackyLogic is really boring, and can't do anything interesting. This isn't (entirely) true. It can be used for more interesting things, [it just takes A LOT of characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86292/55896). However, even after these lots of characters, it is not capable of much computation, it cannot even store the input, most challenges are closed out to it (in fact, the linked example actually checks which year it is, if it divisible by 4, to see if it is a special case (not a leap year))

#### Length 7 Snippet

```
?<
?1
?
```

This program "nests" an OR in a surrounding program. I say it nests it, because if the first bit is 1, it changes to be the exact same as the OR, and executes the same things. This program is (x AND (y OR z))

---

I don't really know anymore decent snippets, there isn't much more to show. I plan on making another answer with my derivative, [Eseljik](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/Eseljik), after I actually make the interpreter, but before that decide on the final part of the spec. Anyway, there are a lot more commands in Eseljik, so I shouldn't easily run out of things to show, like I have here.

Comment: Does StackyLogic fulfill [our definition of programming language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073/36398)?

Comment: No. If this is an issue, maybe you'd prefer HQ9AddPrimality+? Seriously though, perhaps we should not judge on these arbitrary requirements, that try to regulate boring languages, but using common sense to determine what should and shouldn't be allowed. Though this lacks many abilities of normal languages, it is not abusive, like the language HQ9+, and is kind of fun to answer questions with.

Answer (score 6):

## [Woefully](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/Woefully/blob/master/Woefully.py)

Now with [TIO!](http://woefully.tryitonline.net/)

### Factoid:

Woefully is a 2d language with no traditional conditionals (ooh, that rhyme). The closest thing it has to conditionals is the boolean/not_zero command, which pushes `int(stack_A.pop()!=0)`. It's also pretty weird in other ways.

It isn't really possible to even write a program in less than 7 characters, unless you count printing the "error" message as a program, or immediately halting as a program, so perhaps I'll multiply the votes by 4 to get the amount of bytes I can have, if that's allowable (context: it takes 266 bytes to write a truth machine, unless it could be golfed more,)

### 1*4 bytes

```
boom
```

this program technically doesn't error, but just prints "confuse :(", the "error" message of the language, which counts as regular output as it goes to STDOUT, not STDERR. This program doesn't conform to the program composition requirements (needs to have no characters that aren't pipes, spaces and newlines, needs to have at least one space, needs to have no spaces at the start and end of lines), and so automatically prints the message "confuse :("

BTW it is going to be a while before anything really interesting, like even a program that just takes input, or pushes a number, so you might want to look at my [truth machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92377/55896) to see what Woefully looks like

### 2*4 bytes

```
| |
|| |
```

Ooh, we have the first program that doesn't just print "confuse :(" and die. This program does... nothing. It is in an infinite loop of nops

#### Why it nops forever

diagram!

```
v
|\|
||\|
  X
```

The char pointer, the first of two pointers, starts at the character pointed to by v. The instruction pointer will find the first space after this char, and execute the path of spaces it is a part of. The `\` shows the path. the instruction pointer goes down this path, but does nothing, since lines that are two-long are nops. Once it finishes the path, (symbolised by the X), the instruction pointer returns to the char pointer, which has not moved, and executes it again, forever.

### 3*4 bytes

```
| |
| |
| ||
```

This program terminates in an error (not confuse, but an actual error), but why?

three down executes the A to B command, popping the top of the A stack, and pushing it to the B stack. (there are two stacks). However, the program does not immediately fail, because the stacks start with values already on them: one zero each, it runs once normally, then fails the next iteration of the loop.

### 4*4 bytes

```
||| |
|| ||
| ||
```

This program pushes zero to stack A infinitely. this is because all diagonally down left commands push the length of the command, minus three. minus three because a command that is two long is a nop, so the shortest push command is three long, and the smallest push-able value is zero.

### 5*4 bytes

```
| || |
||| ||
|| |||
```

I didn't really have anything interesting (apart from some more erroring commands) to show this time, but I realised none of the snippets halt, though some error, so this snippet just halts, without doing anything (including the push at the right)

#### diagram!

```
v       char pointer starts pointing here
|X||a|   X has the first space after that character, so it's path is executed
|||a|| X halts the program
||a|||   a - never executed
```

Answer (score 6):

## [SX](https://github.com/XiKuuKy/SX)

### Length 1 Code

```
水
```

Compiles to: `pass`

### Length 3 Code

```
10才
```

returns 11. 才 is equivelant to C's ++.

### Length 4 Code

```
品*30
```

returns the circumference of a circle with a diameter. Assuming math was importing.

### Length 5 Code

```
送我(@)
```

compiles to `def __init__(self):print(self)` and will work if put inside a class.

Factoid: sorry pass isn't really that interesting. Sorta interesting, SX is one of the first golfing langauges (I made it when I was in 7th or 8th grade. It also compiles to python.

Answer (score 6):

## [Dotsplit](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/dotsplit)

(whoops I forgot the link before :p)

### (pair of) Factoid(s):

Dotsplit is a mostly syntax free language, with odd builtins (kind of like mathematica), but is currently in it's infancy. Dotsplit is named after the tokeniser used in the interpreter: `str.split()`. This is a weak tokeniser, but it fulfills all needs of the language, so far anyway.

### 1 byte:

```
D
```

`D` does

...

nothing. it isn't a tiny builtin, unless you count a nop as a builtin, and it's only a nop because it isn't a defined command. Dotsplit has relatively long command names for most things. Note that the shortest happens to be three long. anything that isn't a defined command is ignored. also note commands are case insensitive, so if it were a command, `d` would be the same as `D`

### 2 bytes:

still not much interesting

```
 b
```

b with a leading space. This program functions identically to `b`, as well as `D`, because nops, but if `b` was a command, `b` and `D` would not be the same, but `b` and `[space]b` would. Spaces are used to separate commands, but otherwise are ignored. Next upvote, and we get an actual command!

### 3 bytes

First command!

```
aDd
```

This will pop a and b, and push a+b. Popping from an empty stack yields 0.
hence, this program will leave one 0 on the stack. `add` is case insensitive, and will function regardless of case (`AdD` will also work)

### 4 bytes

There are a fair amount more commands with 4 bytes, not many still. I chose this one

```
derp
```

This program will wait for input by the user. If input is "derp" (case-sensitive), it prints "Derp". Otherwise, "Nope"

Comment: That `derp` though...

Answer (score 6):

## Attache

Factoid: This language originally started out as a joke, based on the "Mathematica has builtins for everything"; this can be seen by the residual `Rot` command, made for `Rot13` and similar challenges.

### Length 0 snippet

The empty program is valid in Attache. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP0PBAA)

### Length 1 snippet

```
V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/P@x/QFFmXkm0Qli0oY6CkY6CcaxC7H8A) The `V` function was one of the first implemented. It represents a `V`ector of values, and used to be the only way to create array literals.

### Length 2 snippet

```
`+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/P0H7f0BRZl5JtEKCdrShjoJRrELsfwA)

This is a quoted operator; it acts just as a function which performs addition. It can be assigned like so:

```
f := `+
Print[ f[1, 2] ]
?? prints 3
```

#### Length 3 snippet

```
1:9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/39DK8n9AUWZeSbQCkKkQ@x8A) This is a demonstration fo the range operator in Attache. Attache's main focus resides in generation and selection, as is common with functional languages.

#### Length 4 snippet

```
Bond
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/3yk/L@V/moKVrQKIFZ2gr6NgGMsVUJSZVxKtkBZtGqsQ@x8A) `Bond` is a function used to partially call functions. In this case, `Bond[f, n]` returns a function which takes arguments `...x` and calls `f[...x, n]`. In the link, this is shown by example:

```
f := Bond[`/, 1]
```

This function returns a function which returns the reciprocal of the input. This is roughly equivalent to the lambda:

```
{ _ / 1 }
```

…but we'll get to that next.

#### Length 5 snippet

```
{_2-_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@7863kg3vvZ/QFFmXkm0Qlq0sY6CWaxC7H8A) This is a lambda function, which can be called with any amount of arguments. These arguments are accessible using *blanks*, with `_N` referring to the `N`th argument, starting at `_1`. `_` is short from `_1`. So, this function can be written as:

```
{ _2 - _1 }
```

This is the 1st argument subtracted from the 2nd. In the example, we assign this function to `f`. Then, `f[3, 6]` is `6 - 3`, which evaluates to `3`.

#### Length 7 snippet

```
Print!7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/P6AoM69E0fz/fwA) This shows the operator form of `!`, which takes a function on the left and an argument on the right. It's equivalent to function calling. This calls the inbuilt `Print` function with input `7`, which outputs `7`.

#### Length 8 snippet

```
~{-_'_2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@7@uWjdePd6o9n9AUWZeSXRatKGOglFs7H8A) This demonstrates a few more operators in Attache. First, `~`, when used functionally, reverses the operands given to a function. So, for example, `(~V)[1, 2, 3]` would be called as `V[3, 2, 1]`, which gives `[3, 2, 1]`. `~` has the effect of reversing the order in which abstracts are called. The above function could be rewritten as:

```
{-_2'_}
```

Now, the `'` operator, when used on data, concatenates them. Since `-` is unary, it negates `_2`. This is equivalent to:

```
{ [ -_2, _1 ] }
```

Assign it as `f`, and `f[1, 2]` becomes `[-2, 1]`.

#### Length 9 snippet

```
{Sum!_&_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@786uDRXMV4tvvZ/QFFmXkl0WrRFbOx/AA)

`&` when using data, `a&b`, creates an array of `a` copies of `b`. So, `_&_` creates `_` copies of `_`. `4&4` is, for example, `[4, 4, 4, 4]`. Then, `Sum` is called on that array. Thus, this squares a number.

Answer (score 6):

## [International Phonetic Esoteric Language](https://github.com/bigyihsuan/International-Phonetic-Esoteric-Language)

### Factoid

The International Phonetic Esoteric Language, or IPEL, is a stack-based esolang where the instruction set mostly consists of characters from the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet), and some ASCII.

IPEL is an attempt to apply stuff I've learned from some CS courses since starting college, as well as to create a language for myself for code golf.

### Length 1

```
1
```

IPEL has 3 types: numbers, strings, and lists. Numbers from 0-9 can be pushed in by using the digit.

### Length 2

```
io
```

A simple cat program. `i` takes a string from STDIN, then outputs it with `o`.

### Length 3

```
"a"
```

Pushes the string `a`.

### Length 4

```
1esø
```

This code increments the loop index by 1. In IPEL, loops are not handled by the interpreter; the programmer has to manually set the loop index. Loops also only check for when \$index \lt end\$, where when true, jumps back to the start of the loop.

### Length 5

```
<f>/\
```

An empty function definition.

### Length 6

```
{12.34}
```

This is how you push a float and any numbers larger than 9. Surround it in curly brackets.

### Length 7

```
|a|ɔ|a|
```

Labels also exist in IPEL. When execution hits `ɔ`, it will jump to the label specified right after the `ɔ`. This is also the shortest infinite loop you can do in IPEL.

### Length 8

```
"C"ʁ2zχo
```

This is my answer to the ["A Without A"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/90349/the-letter-a-without-a/193738#193738) challenge. It pushes `C`, converts it to a number, subtracts 2, converts it back to a string, and prints.

### Length 9

```
{zzzzzzz}
```

IPEL since v1.4.0 includes the ability to push base 36 numbers. `zzzzzzz` is equivalent to `78364164095` in base 36.

### Length 17

```
<f>/1ue2sø\<f>2u3u
```

This is the shortest program that demonstrates changing the return pointer of a function call. Without `e2sø`, this would print `123`. With it would print `13` instead, completely skipping the 2 instructions `2u`. I'm not sure if there's any practical use for this, but it's a thing you can do.

Answer (score 5):

## [PyCal](http://github.com/m654z/PyCal)

**Factoid:**

PyCal is a math-based programming language written in Python, hence the name. It's designed to compete in code-golf challenges that need math.

**Length 1 snippet**

```
!
```

OK, let me explain a little about PyCal. PyCal has two "variables". One variable's value can be set by the user. The other variable's value comes from the values that some commands return. For example, the `F` returns the *n*th Fibonacci number.

Anyways, the `!` command outputs the value that is in the user-set variable. By default, it's 0, so the above snippet outputs 0.

**Length 2 snippet**

```
IP
```

This snippet outputs the first *n* prime numbers as a list.

Let me explain what this does:

`I` gets input, and converts it to an integer before storing it in the variable. (From now on, I'll call the variable that the user can change "variable". The other one will be called the result. Read snippet 1 for more info)

`P` takes the variable's value and prints *n* prime numbers. For example, if the value is 5, it will output the first 5 primes.

So, here's what it will look like if the input is 10:

`[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]`

**Length 3 snippet**

```
(7)
```

Ah, it's good to be back, I took a long break.

Anyways, let's get on with the explanation. Well, this is actually really simple. It changes the value of the variable to 7. Of course, this doesn't output anything. You can add a `!` to the end to output the number.

**Length 4 snippet**

(wip)

**Length 5 snippet**

```
(i)S!
```

This snippet gets the square root of the input. `(i)` sets the value of the variable to the input and converts it into an integer. `S` calculates the square root.

Comment: I didn't think it would be Python + Math, I thought it would end up being Python + Pascal...

Comment: @XiKuuKy It's Python + Calculator. PyMath and Pyth (:P) are both taken

Answer (score 5):

## Arithmescript

Making an entry for Arithmescript here.

### Codes

> #### Length 1 snippet
>
> ```
> i
> ```
>
> Prints the value of `i` in the console.

### Factoids

- I am the creator of Arithmescript.
- Arithmescript extends JavaScript.
- It is sort of discontinued.

### Demos

You can try out code in the latest version of Arithmescript at [the official site](https://iap-reloaded.github.io/Arithmescript/).

Comment: Will you add snippets 2-4?

Answer (score 5):

## [Straw](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/straw)

Straw is a 1D stack-based language I created.
It mainly operate on strings.
You can try it online [here](http://straw.tryitonline.net/).

#### Length 1

```
<
```

Take one line of input and exit.

#### Length 2

```
->
```

`-` take an item from the secondary stack, and `>` print it.
Straw have 2 stacks: The first is initialized with an empty string, and the second with `Hello, World!`.
So this code prints `Hello, World!`.

#### Length 3

```
9#>
```

Any character which is not a command is pushed on the stack, and `#` convert a decimal number to unary. It's needed to make any operations on numbers, because Straw don't have numbers, it only operate on strings. So this example prints `000000000`.

#### Length 4

```
<<+>
```

Take two lines of input, concatenate (`+`) and print.

Answer (score 5):

### [FEU](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/feu)

FEU (File Edition Utility) is a heavily regex-based language to edit files.

#### 0 bytes

Cat program. Yep.

In FEU, the input is took implicitely at the start of the program anv every command works on the input. The input is printed at the end.

#### 1 byte

```
/
```

`/` execute the next block each time the input match a regex. Here, it will crash anyway because the block is not closed (`end`).

#### 2 bytes

```
u/
```

The command `u` convert the input to unary, and the input is implicitely printed.

#### 3 bytes

```
s/a
```

`s` is the substitution command, so this remove the first `a` in the input.

Empty fields are optional.

Answer (score 5):

### [D2](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/d2)

#### Factoid

D2 is a Brainfuck-like turing tarpit with a 2D memory model

#### Length 1

```
.
```

This prints `0`. Why?

`.` is, like in Brainfuck, the print command. But since cells are limited to 36 values, D2 use a shift-state system to print most ASCII characters. In shift state 0, the alphabet is `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`, and since the cell is initialized to `0`, this print `0`.

#### Length 2

```
;.
```

Now this print `!`.

The `;` instruction increment the shift state. In shift state 1, the alphabet is `!@#$%^&*()ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`, so this print `!` because the current cell is `0`.

#### Length 3

```
>}+
```

Explanation:

```
>   Turn the cursor 90° to the right
 }  Advance in the tape
  + Increment the pointed cell
```

So the memory after this is:

```
0
1
```

This demonstrate D2's 2D tape

#### Length 4

```
+$}^
```

This set the first cell of the tape to `1`, put the value in the register, advance one cell and put the value of the register in the cell.

Answer (score 5):

## [Octopen-Baru](https://github.com/XiKuuKy/octopen-baru/)

Please note, this is a noncompeting answer because this langauge came out a few minutes ago.

### Length 1 Code

```
見
```

Simple Quine, the Ruby output is `puts('見')`.

### Length 2 Code

```
倍五
```

Which returns `100 .chr` (which is `'d'`).

### Length 3

```
5那}
```

Which returns `5.times {}`, so essentially do nothing five times!

### Length 4

```
口同愛r
```

Which returns `r=gets;puts r`, so it takes whatever you input and gives it back!

### Factoid!

This language has no purposeful use of the newline character. Also, all the commands come from Kanji/中文. Also still under active development.

Comment: Noncompeting answers are allowed, as this is a catalog.

Answer (score 5):

### [Alphafuck](https://github.com/betseg/Alphafuck)

*I'll use `upvote * 2` because this language uses pairs*

**Length 6 snippet**

`noT INF`

This is a infinite loop. Transpiles to `-[]`.

**Length 4 snippet**

`uMhM`

Reads a letter and prints it. Transpiles to `,.`.
This does the same thing: `uM hM`.

**Length 2 snippet**

`um`

Now we're getting into things. This snippet transpiles into Branfuck `+`, which increments the current memory cell by one.

**Length 1 snippet**

`1`

Anything that isn't an letter is ignored. This snippet is basically a comment.

**Factoid**

Alphafuck is an esolang I made that transpiles to Brainfuck.

Answer (score 5):

## [FurryScript](https://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Zzo38/FurryScript)

#### Factoid

FurryScript was made for random text generation. It has some unusual features, such as:

- No negative integer literals
- Subtraction, but no addition
- The return value of a subroutine is "OK", "bad", or "very bad"

[Test snippets here.](http://zzo38computer.org/furry/custom.php)

#### Length 1

```
1
```

An integer literal. This won't really output anything, because first you have to convert it to a string. This can be done by appending an empty string:

```
1 +<>
```

#### Length 2

```
SU
```

Subtraction. Pops two values `y` and `x` and pushes `x` subtracted from `y`. For example, this:

```
6 5 SU +<>
```

outputs this:

```
1
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Bitwise Cyclic Tag](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bitwise_Cyclic_Tag)

#### Factoid:

Bitwise Cyclic Tag is a programming language with only two commands, `0` and `1`. It operates on an unbounded tape of bits and is *somehow* Turing-complete...? I don't yet understand this, but I'll be learning the language along with all of you. Bitwise Cyclic Tag is incredibly simple, even compared to brainfuck and other Turing tarpits, making it a very useful tool for proving other languages' Turing-completeness—if it can interpret BCT, it can do *anything*! In fact, our very own [Ørjan Johansen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66041/%C3%98rjan-johansen) did just this to prove [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////) Turing-complete in 2009, writing [this interpreter](http://oerjan.nvg.org/esoteric/slashes/bct.sss).

#### Length 1 snippet

```
0
```

This here is half of the language. When a zero bit is encountered in the code, the first bit of the data tape is discarded (some implementations print it as well). That's it.

This program demonstrates an important feature of BCT: the code is not run just once, but over and over until the data tape is empty (hence, "cyclic"), at which point execution halts. Therefore, this 0.125-byte program can be considered a sort of cat program, as in any implementation that prints on discard, this will print the entire starting data tape in order and exit gracefully.

#### Length 1 snippet

```
1
```

This here is the other command in BCT. It's a touch more complicated. When a one bit is encountered in the code, if the first data bit is a one, the following bit in the code is appended to the data (on the end). If the first data bit is a zero, nothing happens. In either case, the bit in the code immediately following the `1` is skipped.

It is worth noting that I was not completely honest about repeated execution in the first snippet. The code is treated as a loop (think Haskell's `repeat`), so if this snippet is executed, the bit possibly written is the `1` itself. This snippet, then, will infinitely add ones to the end of the data if the tape starts with a `1` or do nothing forever otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

## [Keg](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg)

#### Factoid

Keg is a stack-based golfing language, created by PPCG user [Lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/jono-2906), that focuses on simplicity and readability. It is fairly unique compared to most other golfing-based languages, since it has few instructions, and alpha-numeric characters are automatically pushed to the stack. It also has implicit input and output.

#### Length One

```
"
```

An example of the stack controls in Keg. This rolls the stack, which puts the top of the stack to the bottom. It is the opposite of `'`, which rolls the stack in the opposite direction, putting the bottom of the stack at the top.

#### Length Two

```
ab
```

Since these are alpha-numeric characters, they get auto-pushed to the stack as their respective ASCII values, which in this case are 97 and 98.

#### Length Two (bytes)

```
ߞ
```

Since this is not an instruction, this will be pushed onto the stack automatically. Keg allows Unicode characters to be pushed onto the stack, so this pushes 2014.

#### Length Three

```
83*
```

Any numbers get auto-pushed to the stack. In this case, it pushes 8, then pushes 3, and then multiplies them, giving 24.

#### Length Four

```
¿:+.
```

This shows how duplicating items and integer printing works by using nice input (evaluation of input) to double the given number.

#### Length Five

```
[a|b]
```

An example of an if statement in Keg. When an if statement is run, the top item of the stack is popped. If it is non-zero, the left code is run, whilst if it is zero, the right on the right is run. Note that the right side is optional

#### Length Six

```
(56*|1
```

An example of a for loop in Keg. The number on the left side is how many times it'll run, whilst the code on the right is what's run. In this case, it pushes 1 to the stack 30 times. If the left side isn't specified, it will automatically be the length of the stack. Also, all ending brackets get automatically completed at the end of the program, making this valid.

#### Length Seven

```
{!4>|.}
```

An example of a while loop in Keg. The code on the left is the condition, and the code on the right is what's run. In this case, while the length of the stack is greater than 4, it outputs the top element of the stack as an integer.

#### Length Eight

```
\ 
& &:.&
```

This demonstrates a unique features of escaping characters and accumulator usage. The \ instruction escapes the newline, which has an ASCII value of 10, then the accumulator is set to 10. After that, the accumulator value will be accessed and printed, resulting in the program printing 10.

#### Length Nine

```
`Snippet`
```

This demonstrates the usage of strings in Keg. It pushes the string "snippet" and prints it.

#### Length Eleven

```
^!~$%(_|")_
```

This showcases most of the commands in one concise program. This removes exactly 1 character from 1 line of input randomly.

#### Length Twelve

```
@d1|:+ƒ¿@dƒ.
```

This defines a function called `d` and assigns the code `:+` to it (doubling the input passed to it). Nice input is then taken (`¿`) and `d` is called on the input.

#### Keg Related Links

[Esolangs Page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg)

[Official Github](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg)

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/#keg)

[Keg Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97278/the-sixth-barrel)

Answer (score 4):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn)

Arn is a golfing language I designed recently. It's a functional paradigm with variable-based storage, and has a few cool features I enjoy. The full syntax can be found by clicking the name at the top of this post. An online interpreter can be found [here](https://zippymagician.github.io) for those interested.

## Features

### Type casting

Arn will automatically cast types based on the following:

- Arrays casting to Strings or Ints will take the 0th element.
- Strings or Ints casting to Arrays will split on every character OR every space if there are any.

### Assumptions

The variable **_** will be automatically assumed in any place where one a value is missing but required.

Similarly, any closing **)**, **]**, **}**, **"**, **'**, or **`** can be ignored if it reaches the end of an expression or the program.

### STDIN

STDIN will automatically be assigned to the variable **_** at runtime. It will be a string if STDIN is one line, or an array split on newlines otherwise.

### Functions

Since functions exist in this language, and that means a **Standard Library** can exist! You will see example functions for that later.

### Packing

In order to help **Arn** compete with other, golfing languages, a packed form exists. This form is shorter, encoded based on a modified **CP1252** found [here](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn). The average compression rate, as far as I've found, is ~17%.

I am very happy with the encoding, I spent hours and hours on it. It may change to become every more concise in the future (if possible, and if I can figure out how) but until then, this will be how it works.

The interpreter can run **Carn** (Compressed Arn) and regular **Arn** without any indication of which is passed.

### Compressed Strings

Should be pretty self explanatory. They are based on a dictionary found [here](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/blob/master/src/dictionary.js).

The code is `F * 100 + S` OR `F * 100`, depending on if 1 valid compressed character or 2 are passed. Compressed strings are denoted with either **'** or **`**, where the former capitalized every word and the latter just the first. You can find a full description on the GitHub page, linked at the top of the post.

## Showcase

From top to bottom.

### 1 byte

```
_
```

This is a very simple program, it will just return STDIN. Output is implicit in this language.

### 2 bytes

```
+4
```

This program will add 4 to STDIN and return it. The same as saying `_ + 4`

### 3 bytes

```
4,7
```

Above features the use of an infix; specifically, the **,** infix. This infix is the pair verb; it takes the left and right argument, turning them into an array.

### 5 bytes

```
.fact
```

This little snippet shows us two new features (three, really!): the **.** infix, the **fact** function, and implicit casting. Since no value is passed to the **.** fix, it assumes **_** on the left. This is then passed to the factorial function. The factorial function uses the **1-range** fix, which takes an integer, and so **_** is automatically casted to an integer.

### 7 bytes

```
+{+1}\~
```

This showcases the extremely useful `\` prefix. This prefix operates as both a fold and map fix; it will map using the block preceding it (if provided) and then fold with the fixes preceding *that*. This snippet also shows the **1-range** fix, `~`, in action.

Essentially, this program takes a number on STDIN. It creates a range, from [1, n] (where n is the input). Then it maps over this range, incrementing each entry by one. Finally, it adds all of the entries together.

Answer (score 3):

## [SQF](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/SQF_syntax)

**Factoid:**

SQF (Status Quo Function) is the scripting language for the Real Virtuality engines (O:FP, ArmA, ArmA 2, ArmA 3). The games written for the engine are functionally just mods made in SQF.

**Length 0 Snippet:**

This is technically valid SQF, and does nothing unless it is treated as code, in which case it is a no-op.

**Length 1 Snippet:**

```
+
```

`+` does the usual things in SQF:

- Concatenation of arrays
- Concatenation of strings
- Addition of numbers

And something really cool as well:

- Deep-copying of arrays (as a unary prefix)

**Length 2 Snippet:**

```
_x
```

`_x` is a magic variable which is used in these cases:

- The current element in the optional predicate block argument of `count` (an array function)
- The current element in the main block of a `forEach` block

**Length 3 Snippet:**

```
a-b
```

This subtracts `b` from `a`, if the operation is applicable to the types of `a` and `b`.
Like quite a few things in SQF, it does something particularly neat with arrays:

- When `a` and `b` are arrays, the result of `a-b` is the set exclusion of `b` from `a`

Answer (score 3):

### [Logy](https://github.com/logy-lang/logy)

Logy is a logic, imperative and functional programming language.

#### 0 bytes

A program without the `main` rule do nothing.

#### 1 byte

```
#
```

Start a line comment

#### 2 bytes

```
->
```

The rule definition operator

Answer (score 3):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy)

### Info:

*Pushy was never meant to be a language.* It was originally just a postfix expression calculator, implemented with a stack. However, I (FlipTack) expanded it, adding several built-ins, loops, and (sort of) strings, it evolved into a language.

### Snippets:

*Note: in the showcase update, all answers are CW, so feel free to contribute to this post! Also, snippet length is no longer restricted by vote count.*

Click on the header of any snippet to run it in the online interpreter!

---

### [Length 7 Snippet:](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@29pqmZsEq/0/z8A)

```
95&34_"
```

This program is the beginning in a chain of programs which output larger versions of themselves.

This program pushes `95`, copies (`&`) it, then pushes `34`. `_` prints the stack's values, and `"` prints it again but as a string, resulting in:

```
95 95 34
__"
```

Which in turn outputs:

```
95 95 34
95 95 34
__"
```

5 or so iterations later, it looks like this:

```
95 95 34 95 95 34 95 95 34 95 95 34
95 95 34 95 95 34 95 95 34 95 95 34
__"__"__"__"
95 95 34 95 95 34 95 95 34 95 95 34
95 95 34 95 95 34 95 95 34 95 95 34
__"__"__"__"
```

...and it keeps growing forever. (If you iterate ~8 times, TIO begins to [cut the output](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@m9pqgBExiYKlDG4AKOWOfHxSlgR16hDRx06OBiDzj24Am40QEcDdDRARwMUFKD//wMA))

---

### [Length 3 Snippet:](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@2/lofT//39TAA)

```
:H"
```

This is in fact an adaption of my [asterisk triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104293/60919) answer. Given an integer, for example `n = 5`, it prints a "d-triangle" of this size:

```
d
dd
ddd
dddd
ddddd
```

This is a concise example of both loops and char-code conversion in Pushy:

```
:    \ Input times do (consuming input):
 H   \   Push 100 to the stack (character code for 'd')
  "  \   Print the whole stack, as a string.
```

As each iteration pushes a new `'d'`, this creates a triangle.

Notice there is no "end-loop" delimiter: this is normally signified with a `;`. However, the interpreter automatically assumes these to be at the end of the program if omitted.

---

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

## tinylisp

### Factoid:

`tinylisp` is a language made by @DLosc for an "interpret this language" challenge. Its intent is to demonstrate what a Lisp-like language can do using only very few builtins.

[Here](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/blob/master/tinylisp/tinylisp.py) is an interpreter.

### Snippet 1:

```
d
```

This single character is perhaps the most used builtin in tinylisp: the `def` builtin. It can be used to define variables and functions, and is basically required for every tinylisp program. Like any other lisp-like language, you define things like this:

```
(d x 10) // Creates a new variable x, and sets it to 10
(d succ  // Successor function, will be properly covered later
  (q (
    (x)
    (s 1 (s 0 x)))))
```

---

### Snippet 2:

```
()
```

Everything in tinylisp (and basically most Lisp-like languages) are built off of parentheses. In tinylisp, these parentheses define an empty list - which is one of three data types in tinylisp:

- Symbols
- Numbers (which will be covered in the next snippet)
- Lists

---

### Snippet 3:

```
1.5
```

tinylisp has numbers, but surprisingly enough, this is not a number. Numbers (at least, numbers you can type down before compilation) in tinylisp only have the characters `0-9` in them, and anything else is a name, so these "numbers" aren't numbers in tinylisp:

```
-13    (contains -)
.335   (contains .)
17,232 (contains ,)
```

*There's currently no way to define floats in tinylisp, however I'm working on implementing a fraction "class" thing in tinylisp. - Qwerp-Derp*

---

### Snippet 4:

```
disp
```

This is a four-character builtin in tinylisp, however most builtins are only one character (see snippet `1` for an example). This basically returns a value to STDOUT, with a trailing newline.

---

### Snippet 5:

```
(v 1)
```

Yes, finally, a full statement that actually evaluates to something!

This e`v`aluates the number `1`, and therefore returns `1`. That's simple enough - more complicated examples are to come.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/tinylisp#@69RpmCo@f8/AA) (from snippet 5 onwards, you should be able to test all of the programs).

---

### Snippet 6:

```
(q(1))
```

This snippet `q`uotes the list `(1)`, and therefore evaluates to `(1)`. I'm doing the best I can with 6 bytes...

`q` basically takes anything, and then returns the same thing, unevaluated. So for a program like this:

```
(q (s 1 2))
```

Instead of returning `3`, it returns `(s 1 2)` instead.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/tinylisp#@69RqGGoqfn/PwA)

---

### Snippet 7:

```
(s 1 2)
```

`s` is the subtraction builtin; more specifically, it subtracts two integers. The above returns `-1`. Incidentally, `s` is the only way to get negative numbers in tinylisp (compare snippet 3).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/tinylisp#@69RrGCoYKT5/z8A)

---

### Snippet 8:

```
(q(()1))
```

This is the simplest example of a lambda in tinylisp, and is essential to both evaluating other things and creating functions. The structure of lambdas is like so:

```
(q (  ;; Lambdas have to be quoted using "q", so not to get evaluated
  ()  ;; A list of arguments, in this example there are 0 args, so
      ;; this is an empty list
  1   ;; The "body" of the lambda: in this case, we're returning 1
      ;; for every input.
))
```

This statement is essentially similar to the Python lambda `lambda:1` (which is also 8 bytes long, coincidentally). It can be used like so:

```
( (q(()1)) )  ;; evaluates to 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/tinylisp#@6@hoFGooaFpqKmpoPn/PwA)

Comment: You don't actually say how to define floats. What if I *want* to enter 1.5?

Comment: @Pavel There's no way to define floats in tinylisp, unfortunately... :p

Answer (score 3):

## [Triangularity](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Triangularity)

#### Factoid

Triangularity is a minimalistic esolang, which can (for now) only perform very basic arithmetic and string / list manipulation. As its name might suggest, every piece of code should be padded nicely with triangles of dots. Valid Triagularity programs must have the *character* count listed in [OEIS A056220](https://oeis.org/A056220) (except for -1), otherwise you are probably doing something wrong.

#### [Length 1](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/X/P/fwA)

```
)
```

This just pushes a `0` onto the stack, and the top of the stack is implicitly outputted.

#### [Length 7](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/X09Tj8vTteD/f0NjAA)

```
.).
IEp
```

First off, `)` pushes a **0** onto the stack, the argument to `I`, which retrieves the **0**th line from STDIN. `E` evaluates it to an integer and finally `p` tests our integer for primality.

#### [Length 17](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/X09PU0@PS8/TVVOPy8HTVVvv/39DYy5DUwA)

```
..)..
.IE).
@IE+.
```

Adds any two valid inputs, either numbers or collections.

#### [Length 31](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/X09PTxOIufT0PF01QbSBnaZDvB5XnKanq76e3v//uuYA)

```
...)...
..IE)..
.0>)@_.
^)IE/..
```

Computes the absolute value of a number, by multiplying by its sign, with a few tweaks.

#### [Length 49](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/Xw8INEEEFxAbaRpCWPoump6uIFZcZrGmA5DJFZdpqwcG//@bcZkCAA)

```
....)....
...2)1...
../D)IE..
.^is)@IE.
^i=......
```

Checks if the integer part of the square root of two numbers given as input is identical.

#### [Length 71](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/Xw8EFMAkF4hQUlSCsZVyUpS0IWwlhfD8IhCHS0/JIzUnJ18HyAGrh4L//wE)

```
..... .....
...."!"....
..."ld"+...
.." Wor"+..
."Hello,"+.
...........
```

Of course, we need a "Hello, World!" program! This can actually be golfed down to 49 bytes

```
.... ....
..."!"...
.."ld"+..
." Wor"+.
"Hello,"+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/Xw8IFEAEFxArKSpBWEo5KUraIJaSQnh@EZDJpeSRmpOTr6Ok/f8/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## dotcomma

Dotcomma is a simple esolang I made, which uses only 4 instructions and <s>is not Turing complete</s> is now Turing complete, due to the addition of a queue for storage.

**Factoid:**

With only the instructions `[.,]`, the `.` and `,` operators are heavily overloaded. For example, `,` can take input and output, manage the queue, test the number of times a code block was evaluated, and conditionally evaluate a code block. Which of these occur is decided by what characters precede and follow an operator.

**Length 2 snippet:**

All dotcomma programs are wrapped in code blocks (`[]`), so a length 1 snippet is impossible.

```
[]
```

This program does nothing.

**Length 3 snippet:**

```
[.]
```

This program sets its return value to 1. All operators and blocks have a return value, which can be used by other operators and blocks to nest expressions, create loops, or manage the programs's structure. If the `.` operator is preceded by `[`, it's return value is `1`. If followed by a `]`, it uses its return value as the block's return value.

**Length 3 snippet:**

```
[,]
```

This program would previously take a value from input, and output it. The return value of the `,` operator would have been taken from input when preceded by `[`, and outputted if followed by `]`.

In "modern" dotcomma, this will take a value from the queue, and place it at the end of the queue. For example, given the input `6 7 8` (input is placed on the queue by default), this program would output `7 8 6` (final value of the queue is used as output by default).

Like the `.` operator, `,` will use its return value as a block's return value if followed by `]`.

**Length 4 snippet:**

```
[.,]
```

This program will output `1`. As with the second snippet, the `.`'s return value is set to `1`. However, because the `,` operator is preceded by an operator, it will use that operator's return value instead of taking a value from the queue.

**Length 5 snippet:**

```
[[,]]
```

This program will take a value from the queue, and place it back on the queue. However, it will have a return value of 0. This is because the `,` is wrapped in a nested block, and blocks default to a return value of 0 if an operator does not explicitly define one.

**Length 6 snippet:**

```
[[,].]
```

This program does the exact same thing as `[,]`. The `.` operator, if preceded by `]`, will set its return value to the sum of the return values of all previous un-separated blocks, which is only one in this case.

**Length 9 snippet:**

```
[[].[],.]
```

This will return the -1. The first empty block's return value will be read by `.`, which returns 0. As a result, the next block will be skipped (a loop that runs 0 times). Because the block preceding the `,` was never run, its return value will be -1.

**Length 11 snippet:**

```
[[,.][,.].]
```

This program uses the `.` operator's addition capabilities to take the sum of two inputs and use it as the program's exit code. Adding a `.` to the end of the `,` operators will prevent them from outputting, as they are no longer followed by `]`.

Comment: I already made a few answers using dotcomma, and for me it's a really interesting language. However, I'd like to suggest some improvements. I think the language would be more fun if you'd allow negative values on the queue. Of course that change would need a different option to determine if the queue is empty. My idea is to use `..` and `,,`, since those combinations aren't particularly useful in the current implementation. You could for example use `,,` to return the length of the queue and `..` to return the negative of the previous value, and then return 0 if you read from an empty queue.

Answer (score 3):

## [Integral](https://github.com/nph278/integral)

Integral is a stack-based golfing language I recently made. It uses code page 437.

An [interpreter](https://a-ee.github.io/integral/main.html).

### 1 byte

```
V
```

Integral has many built-in functions. `V` reverses the top of the stack. Integral pushes all input to the stack and implicitly outputs the stack seperated by newlines.

### 12 bytes

```
÷▓ll▄å▒▌«s»÷
```

You can compress strings in Integral. This ouputs `hello there person`. Compressed strings are started and ended by `÷`.

### 37 bytes

```
♂⌡ ⌡♦⌡_⌡g►⌡/⌡•⌡ ⌡g►⌡\⌡►•⌡|⌡♦⌡ ⌡g►⌡|⌡►
```

This is an example program that takes an integer as input, and returns an ASCII-art rainbow with width n.

I do not think Integral is Turing-Complete yet.

Comment: You probably want to update the 12 byter to [`÷▌lloª• pô┼÷` (12 bytes)](https://a-ee.github.io/integral/?code=9t1sbG+mByBwk8X2&input=)

Comment: @petStorm The interpreter needs to be fixed first.

Comment: Interpreter fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## [NO!](https://github.com/ValyrioCode/NO)

### Factoid

The only valid characters in NO! are `NOno!?`. This language was created 2 hours ago and I'm currently writing this with my 12th cup of coffee in my hand. This language is close to the antithesis of code golf as demonstrated by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114877/66833) answer to the `Hello, World!` challenge.

### Snippets

#### *Hello, World!*

```
NOOOOOOOOO?Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
NOOOOOOOO?no
```

#### *Add two numbers*

```
NO?NOOOOOOOOOOO!NOOOOOOOOOOO
NOOOOOOOO?no
```

#### *Prime Tester*

```
NOOOOOOO?NOOOOOOOOOOO
NOOOOOOOO?no
```

Answer (score 2):

## [CGL (CGL Golfing Language)](https://codepen.io/programmer5000/pen/zwYrVd)

<sub>(or Code Golf Language, this was not intentional :)</sub>

### Factoid

CGL uses the stack concept like a lot of other golfing languages, but unlike them it has an infinite number of stacks that it has. Most operators operate on the current stack except some that change the current stack or move things. Stacks have numerical indexes. 0 is the default stack. The `-1`th stack is where input is stored.

I am unsure how bytes are counted for some of this unicode, so feel free to correct me in comments.

### 1 byte

```
h
```

Outputs `Hello, World!`. Actually pushes `Hello, World!` to the current stack (default `0`) and the first element in the current stack is outputted by default.

### 2 bytes

```
-²
```

There are a lot of possible 2 byte programs, but I wanted to show a cool operator in this one: `-`. `-` decrements the current stack, in this case switching from `0` (default) to `-1` (where input is stored). `²` squares the current stack. The first item in the current stack is outputted by default, so this squares the input and returns it.

### 3 bytes (uses a combining character)

```
'҄҄낄䀀
```

This shows off the neat string compressing function. Normally, you wrap a string in `"`s and it is pushed to the current stack. `'`s enable you to use compressed strings. `҄낄䀀` is the compressed version of `Hi!` (note in this example, there is no compression savings, but with longer strings there often is. Also, you can use `&` to compress the current stack.) Quotes are auto-completed if you leave them off.

### 4 bytes

```
-#2➕
```

Adds 2 to the input. `➕` adds the second stack item to the first or `1` to the first if the second stack item is non-existent.

### 5 bytes

```
-#1＋Ⓧ
```

The `#` pushes the following number to the stack. Note that technically numbers are *wrapped* in #s, but if you leave them off they will be added between the last digit and any non-number character. The `＋` (diffrent from `+`) adds the first 2 stack items and pushes that to the stack. `Ⓧ` outputs the last item from the stack and exits. This therefore adds 1 to the input.

Answer (score 2):

## Decimal

Decimal, also called 09D by some users, is an esoteric stack-based programming language I created that uses only the characters `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, and `D`.

**Factoids**

- Decimal is stringly typed. The `PUSH` code for `STRING` is 3.
- Decimal was on [tio.run](//tio.run/#Decimal) from day 1 of its release.
- Decimal is not based on the top of the stack. It's based on a Default Stack Index (DSI). All functions that write to the stack set this index.
- While very obfuscated, Decimal can be easily translated into pseudo-stack code.
- All characters other than `0`-`9` and `D` are simply printed as they appear in the source code. This excludes whitespace.
- Decimal uses Assembly-like comment syntax, e.g. `;COMMENT`.

The Decimal GitHub repo is [here](//github.com/aaronryank/Decimal).

### Length 1 snippet

`2` is the command for `POP`. Simple enough. `POP` pops the DSI from the stack.

```
2
```

### Length 1 snippet

`5` is the command for `IF`/`ENDIF`.

```
5
```

If not in an if-statement, `5` will check the DSI value. If truthy, the interpreter will continue reading as normal. If falsy, it will ignore all commands until `5`, except `JUMP`. `JUMP` will exit any if-statement.

If currently in an if-statement, `5` acts as `ENDIF`.

### Length 3 snippet

Command `3` is the command for I/O. The first argument specifies where to read from (`0` for stack, `1` for user input). The second argument specifies where to put the read value (`0` for stack, `1` for output).

All I/O commands are 3 characters long.

### Length 3 snippet

Command `9` is the command for `JUMP`. `JUMP` commands must end in the character `D`. `JUMP 0` exits the program.

```
91D
```

If jump #1 has not been declared, `91D` will declare it. If jump #1 *has* been declared, `91D` will jump to it.

### Length 4 snippet

Command `4` is the command for `MATH`. See the [MATH](https://github.com/aaronryank/Decimal#math) section in the Decimal README for more information on `MATH` arguments. Each `MATH` command must end in `D`.

```
412D
```

This compares `STACK[DSI-1]` and `STACK[DSI]` for equality, pops both, and pushes the result.

Answer (score 2):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language/src)

MY currently has no implemented codepage, so code will be listed in both bytes and the unimplemented codepage, one following the other. MY is stack based and "vector oriented" (like Jelly, some commands automatically "vecify" over their arguments). MY also has an "Object Subject Verb" visual order of commands.

### 1 byte

```
27
↵
```

This program outputs `0` with a trailing newline. MY does not have implicit input nor implicit output, if one pops from an empty stack, it pops 0.

### 2 bytes

```
1F 27
⍞↵
```

This program takes a line of raw input, then outputs it (with a trailing newline). MY can't do very much in 1 or 2 bytes due to lack of implicit IO.

### 3 bytes

```
1F 64 27
⍞h↵
```

Reads a line from STDIN, then converts it from hexadecimal (must be uppercase) to an integer. This **beats Jelly**.

### 4 bytes

```
01 02 81 26
12-←
```

This is where the quirk of MY comes in, for multiple argument commands, MY pops the amount of arguments needed, then applies them to a function in the **order that they are popped**. OSV, this resembles (hence, the `Y` standing for `Yoda`). Thus, the above code outputs `1`  rather than `-1` (*without* a trailing newline).

### 5 bytes

```
01 4D 02 80 26
1W2+←
```

This showcases MY's "vector orientation". This differs from APL and J, but is more like Jelly's concept of vectorizing ("vecifying" in MY). The program pushes 1 to the stack, wraps that in an array, pushes 2 to the stack, adds the top two elements, then displays with no newline (outputting `[3]` due to the "vecification" of commands).

Answer (score 2):

## Pain-Flak

Pain-flak is brain-flak's evil sibling, I would just read the docs [here](https://github.com/Cis112233/Pain-Flak)

## 6 Bytes:

```
))((}{
```

That pushes 1 to the stack (stack clean)

## 156 Bytes:

```
><))))))))))))()()()((}{(}{(}{)((((}{}{)((][][][][(][][(]][[)((]][][][][][[)(()‌​])][)][(][][}{([)()()()]][[))])()()([)])][][][([))))}{)((}{(((}{}{(((((}><{
```

The hello world program made by Dennis (run with -A)

Answer (score 2):

## [평범한  한글(Unsuspected-Hangul)](https://github.com/dragonteros/unsuspected-hangeul)

Unsuspected-Hangul is functional esolang.

#### Factoid

Unsuspected-Hangul only uses 10 consonants of Korean character : `ㄱㄴㄷㄹㅁㅂㅅㅇㅈㅎ`, and other consonants are replaced by them. Vowels and final consonants are dismissed. Non-hangul(alphabet, number, white spaces) are all same.

Rule of replacement

```
ㅊ -> ㅈ, ㅋ -> ㄱ, ㅌ -> ㄷ, ㅍ -> ㅂ
ㄲ -> ㄱ, ㄸ -> ㄷ, ㅃ -> ㅂ, ㅆ -> ㅅ, ㅉ -> ㅈ
ㄳ -> ㄱㅅ, ㄵ -> ㄴㅈ, ㄶ -> ㄴㅎ, ㄺ -> ㄹㄱ, ㄻ -> ㄹㅁ, ㄼ -> ㄹㅂ, ㄽ -> ㄹㅅ, ㄾ -> ㄹㄷ, ㄿ -> ㄹㅂ, ㅀ -> ㄹㅎ, ㅄ -> ㅂㅅ
```

[You can try unsuspected-hangul here](https://dragonteros.github.io/unsuspected-hangeul/pbhhg.html)

#### Length 1

```
강
```

`ㄱㄴㄷㄹㅁㅂㅅㅈ` is number : From zero to seven.

Only initial consonant counts : so it is same as `ㄱ`, So it returns 0.

*강 means river.*

#### Legnth 2

```
나무
```

Even-length number is negative, while odd-length number is positive. Every number is octal.

ㄴ is 1, and ㅁ is 7, and it is written backward, so `ㄴㅁ` is `-71`(octal), `-33`(decimal).

*나무 means tree.*

#### Length 3

```
코끼리
```

This is odd-length, so it is positive. It is equivalent of `ㄱㄱㄹ`, `300`(octal), and `192`(decimal).

*코끼리 means elephant.*

#### Length 4

```
집전화기
```

Now introducing : types. Unsuspected-hangul has 7 types : Number, Boolean, String, List, Closure, IO, Nil.

`ㅈㅈ` is built-in function that returns True. And `ㅎㄱ` calls function with 0 parameters.
So `ㅈㅈㅎㄱ` returns `True`.

*집전화기 means Home telephone.*

#### Length 5

```
문자 한개
```

Non-hangul(like space) right before `ㅎ` can be omitted. `ㅁㅈ` is built-in function that changes number to string (if given with parameter). If `ㅁㅈ` called with no parameter, it just returns empty string.

So `ㅁㅈ ㅎㄱ` returns `''`

*문자 한개 means One character.*

#### Length 6

```
평범한 한글
```

Yes, It is name of the language. It is equivalent of `ㅂㅂㅎ ㅎㄱ`.

`ㅎ` makes function. `ㅂㅂ ㅎ`( is `ㅂㅂㅎ`) is function that returns -45.

`ㅎㄱ` calls function with no parameters, so it returns -45.

*평범한 한글 means Ordinary Korean character, or Unsuspected Hangul.*

#### Length 7

```
또 또 신호등
```

`ㄷ ㄷ ㅅㅎㄷ`. `ㅅ` is built-in function for power. `ㅎㄷ` calls function with two parameters. (Remember ㄷ means 2?)

So it calculates 2^2, and returns 4.

*또 또 신호등 means Traffic light again again.*

#### Length 8

```
나 과제 다했다
```

`ㄴ ㄱㅈ ㄷㅎㄷ`. `ㄷ` is built-in function for addition. `ㄱㅈ` is -56, so it calculates 1 + (-56), and returns -55.

*나 과제 다했다 means I'm done with my assignment.*

*From github readme.md file.*

#### Length 9

```
그는 자는 척했다
```

`ㄱㄴ ㅈㄴ ㅈㅎㄷ`. `ㅈ` is built-in function for comparison. If first parameter is smaller than second parameter, returns true. `ㄱㄴ` is -8, and `ㅈㄴ` is -15. So it returns False.

*그는 자는 척했다 means He pretended to sleep.*

Answer (score 2):

## ARM Thumb-2

<sup>*Also applies to [ThumbGolf](https://github.com/easyaspi314/thumbgolf), a direct superset of Thumb-2.*</sup>

ARM Thumb-2 is a rather quirky RISC instruction set. It is a 32-bit architecture, but unlike most RISC instruction sets, it uses a mix of 16-bit and 32-bit instructions.

Thumb was originally a 16-bit only subset of the 32-bit ARM instruction set, created in 1998 with the ARM7TDMI. It was designed for embedded devices which either had a 16-bit memory bus or required more code density, and it was pretty impractical otherwise.

In 2003, with the release of the ARM1156T2, this was expanded to a whole new instruction set, named Thumb-2. Combining flexible 32-bit instructions with the existing 16-bit instructions, Thumb-2 was a faster, smaller, and more polished replacement for the old 32-bit ARM instruction set.

ARM is best known for its powerful addressing modes, barrel shifter, [Absolutely Ridiculous Multiplier](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0489/c/arm-and-thumb-instructions/multiply-instructions), load/store multiple, and conditional execution.

Small factoid: Thumb was a key factor in the Game Boy Advance's design. It significantly lowered the cost of Game Paks thanks to both the code density and the cheap memory bus.

#### Length: 4

```
0841 d3xx
```

```
        lsrs    r1, r0, #1
        bcc     .Lbit_not_set
```

`lsls` and `lsrs` are (likely) the most useful arithmetic instructions out of the original 16-bit instruction set. Many masking operations can be done in half the size with a simple shift right and testing the flags.

This tests if the low bit is set. You can also use this for bitmasks, as `lsrs` and `lsls` also set the zero flag.

#### Length: 6

```
fab0 f080 0940
```

Assembly:

```
        clz     r0, r0
        lsrs    r0, r0, #5
```

I learned this one from Clang.

This sets `r0` to `0` if it was nonzero, or `1` if it was zero.

In C terms, it is `r0 = !r0`.

It does this by counting the leading zeros, which will return a value from 0-32 (with 32 meaning the register is all zero bits), then shifting right to turn 32 to 1 and everything else to 0.

#### Length: 4

```
b100 2001
```

```
        cbz     r0, 1f
        movs    r0, #1
1:
```

The same as above, but sets `r0` to `1` if it is non-zero, or `!!r0`. This shows off the `cbz` (compare and branch if zero) instruction, and is quite literally this:

```c
if (r0 != 0)
    r0 = 1;
```

#### Length: 6

`push` and `pop` are very useful.

```
b40f bc0e bc01
```

```
        push    {r0, r1, r2, r3}
        pop     {r1, r2, r3}
        pop     {r0}
```

This is a similar trick to the `push rax; pop rdx` trick in x86_64 to avoid REX prefixes, however, it is much better:

This rotates the registers `r0-r3`, so `r0` will have `r1`'s value, `r1` will have `r2`'s value, etc. You can do all sorts of tricks.

#### Length: 12

```
ea80 3040 ea80 4050 ea80 1040
```

Assembly:

```c
        // XorShift32
        // in: state: r0
        // out: state: also r0
        // x ^= x << 13
        eor     r0, r0, r0, lsl #13
        // x ^= x >> 17
        eor     r0, r0, r0, lsr #17
        // x ^= x << 5
        eor     r0, r0, r0, lsl #5
```

[XorShift32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift), with **no temporary registers**. This shows off the coolness of ARM's barrel shifter.

#### Length: 18

```
19e0 0269 4066 406f 4075 407c 404e ea4f
5777
```

```c
        // A rather literal translation of xoshiro128+.
        // Input: r4-r7: state
        // Output: r0: result, r4-r7 modified

        // result = s[0] + s[3]
        adds    r0, r4, r7
        // t = s[1] << 9
        lsls    r1, r5, #9
        // xor all state lanes together
        eors    r6, r4
        eors    r7, r5
        eors    r5, r6
        eors    r4, r7
        // xor temp
        eors    r6, r1
        // rotl
        ror     r7, r7, #32 - 11
```

If Xorshift32 is too weak for your tastes, here is its cousin [xoshiro128+](http://prng.di.unimi.it/xoshiro128plus.c). However, it uses most of your precious Lo registers, so it isn't practical as a sub-algorithm. ‍♂️

It stores the state in `r4-r7`, and returns in `r0`. It clobbers `r1`.

Note: [xorshiro64*](http://prng.di.unimi.it/xoroshiro64star.c) is two bytes larger.

#### Length: 12

```
fba0 4502 fb00 5503 fb01 5502
```

```c
        // Standard 64-bit to 64-bit long multiply:
        // input: x[0]: r0, x[1]: r1, y[0]: r2, y[1]: r3
        // output: product[0]: r4, product[1]: r5
        // {r4, r5} = (u64)x[0] * (u64)y[0]
        umull   r4, r5, r0, r2
        // {r4, r5} += (x[0] * y[1]) << 32
        mla     r5, r0, r3, r5
        // {r4, r5} += (x[1] * y[0]) << 32
        mla     r5, r1, r2, r5
```

A 64x64 multiply with a 64-bit result. This shows off the multiply and accumulate instruction, but it gets better:

#### Length: 16

```
fba2 4500 fba2 6201 fbe3 6560 fbe3 2561
```

Commented assembly:

```c
        // Does an unsigned 64-bit to 128-bit long multiply
        // in: x[0]: r0, x[1]: r1, y[0]: r2, y[1]: r3
        // out: product[0]: r4, product[1]: r6, product[2]: r2, product[3]: r5
        // {r4, r5} = (u64)y[0] * (u64)x[0]
        umull   r4, r5, r2, r0
        // {r6, r2} = (u64)y[0] * (u64)x[1]
        umull   r6, r2, r2, r1
        // {r6, r5} = (u64)y[1] * (u64)x[0] + r6 + r5
        umaal   r6, r5, r3, r0
        // {r2, r5} = (u64)y[1] * (u64)x[1] + r2 + r5
        umaal   r2, r5, r3, r1
```

This is a **64-bit to 128-bit** unsigned long multiply. On a 32-bit processor. In four instructions. x86 takes about 30.

See my comment in [xxHash's source code](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash/blob/f2c52f1236a50d754b07f584ce4592de1df8c0f7/xxhash.h#L3272) of the C algorithm which explains this.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem)

Pxem is an esoteric language designed by "ぬこ" (now "nk."), published in 2008. Unlike many other languages, filename matters first and content is second; that is, a Pxem program consists of two strings.

### 0 bytes

If content is empty, calling `.e` is equivalent to duplicating entire stack.

### 1 byte

```
.
```

Every command has this prefix; this may be awkward when you want to push the character directly, on some problems.

### 3 bytes

```
\001.r
```

My favorite idiom to push zero on filename. As filename cannot contain NULL character (usually), this would be needed.

### 4 bytes

```
XX.z
```

My favorite idiom to begin pseudo comment.

### 6 bytes

```
.c.c.z
```

My idiom to check if stack is empty or not; goes inside if stack is empty; does not otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

## [ErrLess](https://sr.ht/%7Eruan_p/Errless/)

### Factoid

ErrLess is a functional language where every command is one character long. Its defining feature is that it refuses to throw any errors, even if you divide by zero!

You can run ErrLess in your browser by inserting your code into the `code` section of [this python program](https://tio.run/##1VvpdtvGFf6vp5hItQFIXJU0TWnTreOtOrEt11Z72lAMDwgMSdgggMwMLVKO87MP0Efsi7j3zgIMFlKyYzWpzhElDGbu/e46dxZmG7FIky@/ydiHA/KYimBBQzJj6ZIshMj4oNudR6LDWWchuj@zlZ9Msi5lLKacTxid8a5glHaXfpR0I0GX3Wk0jxIxWSVRkIa0mynyZkgn2xBfkC975DQQ6ZQyctw77u9FyyxlgvhsnvmMU/PMN9z8K6Il3dsLYp9zEiXZYI/AT0hnZDKJkkhMJi6n8cxT7fiDj53QFz4ZEsfZy/vPqYijhFa7MypWLLFGHSH3DhdhlHQY9UM5yBsN2v1xiZgk1CI8uqTDdt@iGM1kI7lLeoOrybteAQUQ5x1HAyQyvlOSp3iLLwfjqhSsTh47tmOauMzzSvijqiYSOgcWj/0Y7FCDhAL3C6gXiyimhHUizjM/AP0UZHYNA9XAK7BL2xlofmdsRe9cwSdJBWEjMEDBj/hJmLeF4HqijuGomaatUEkBlWbaSpIzZXXTJNimwkJpHdwetIvCIVAUi4IOSVu15yPoOqCZIH/34xV9xFjKGomNwMvAz4E7fIJz7KG54izN3LhFosLTgFvEo4QLPwF9wLs44sI7NyRRPa4bkXtD0pMPEfgjukHseSRlxMVn9cZtRx65OzRv67ERd5B9pCSxYCpklL75FaGNonEjLA42R1Qtsv4fokI4YLm1BUnhmcW@ELJ7DgZ9pQFQnjJGsZYMCI7UvzPAQcEvSGwpokPXQDl0DQvqlQzFFIAgzTY29ybOVeWO5CDqWXxLyo4V6TCdrFyTSKSwE3ddpzaDxga515q7ipkRjN0ohhtkuC4xnE1yjmGNY4tsLKZ@i0wxhuqMWnbjRjfaGcqXRp42RydwumyRCwUR/0OUl1Gm@Be5gsZIaRcNLealJWY@cDtzYHNpDdyMG9SMtKtqUxPocwpyT2M6MO504bMQ1PQup@JcQmZ2vndaRcs7bHlvt7jY4tktS2x5plvey8@pH7ypk99gx3/aQ99jyzu7xcMW1255hi3LnLx0Av4myiZBulxSSLMZS@ctkgnWMlLxIc4sxuGTAGD00brmtc7Rffk@WPgYZkhlBESUUhNQlkzDgXzkgkUJzljYWc2kenaCfoW9YDhOPGaUabql0gVyKJytka3F60gzs5xTDRlKq5R8RKKFAf2yJ@X93zf1b2N/21VcgHEE2L1bOdqWRmNpXevQ1jqSg05DWT60CCSk4fM0Mfrfqt8J@GPwBjMcdhk3KFrLTTEjgwMDzYF8GObO3NFwNImKZRSHmn36N2IdV6sBJwyj@QLEqDdWdYt8BdFblaBsoV3W1sBbZIKFU2MkeLUBBe5J7V2QJgB8RWs@oqB3/CzDSQYBeWUPc1FzRU@PfGFrt5hcq8LKssxSDlRaLWlfDyWWjAbb0GA9UoFRRTHEeM@VDU8A/wp6tUDo7w4Dk@F@K3Fg8Fw/ENq/tUAwImyPhPcfHwkttaj5zQaEEfr/OiLEKgOmH11j4jDqmsFrVdqsZa2pxJGilCnJMQ1rgYbalKXCF3JQml1dejdTrA9IM1O0AljUBxDHBUF/CwWxxPVcvlRKMwyAvKKPUFrmJ3Pq9luGnAUG6jlFAD5bJSrRuDC5WfHIZlz17FVae2NJx2vQ0pz5U5cDbUtNpn3i5k0yZIzjmyUpYlUDcBkgR3g4ROt/pZxlgL4ig3GAy2V0HUxGUotQsq0SPiBhFIBG2/ewgy5QV0kp78jGgwPy6uz@g@/I6YtHL@@fnZw@f7Vn7CQHQJIYQL14QB6kSQDWT@C3WBdIQwB0FRR5@3RLu8xlZev72vhqWVh5OTUvy5FVyhkj6OSP7WjldFDuMiVHxPeqYq2lWPdllyslirdLdKX/1yHHDZBL3WPT1fe2k4lrIt2RIr2iGWXXMVMdvN8IHsePfHumQhR6pexbmcXg@ELieJFmhf4q7Evd/yy7P8S0Fdi4ccGgltoyTNVwb69RGaKB7lzSfQJRlI9Js50GLtjkL1Q4Y5sJ6TqjJzkjtecru1/N0yat/zSSjyX5pzSZi0Vp/6ziD7glYmuqtlt2tsn0Zll5ZLvfwPWpxZWks4pQNc62dUp0mKTzUs4dZZ3k@ziFbrZY18w8RUcrV5a4vbS4NdlhJ0/NZpctWpI@Vht7W2K7IDxuGP87FaIXfvbJWbQUfhiyU7MZDdn8aSQg@GO@V2YNk6LT6x9/@dXvv/7DN3/0pwHMJ0qS1XJKGW8WBvdcYXSL9L9u0vW5o2YGqID8QNhUzLrwzvY6uMQo1XW/nJmaWL1Sajt7efL8yV6pUuWmUm1YR@t1A4zewneEjANVJwWoJD7q4y61lZz15A70ch3fZxuxWPoiCvbqSI/UtBKGv9C@GqHcnYv95TT0sXaBmF8fbTycGf0mPbWVnlZTgSa5MQjtHRAmOkLmdrxXCa5yggPSXnulcGygeShpPlvFIsrizY2JdbhDrK6apKK3UfjpBZBc7fozGkZvq3useU7XDrfudjellzqHf09Ziih4lCY6l@sRvR1yaqbbxbulNJyGqzj9xeIt0/BK8W59ZumA53bpzs@N9aDb57DeNSS0e32kqK3r2NIW2GSmB@ky81nE06QhMw2lDh79uPLjSNxYELX7h@56ONx4261xV1cWnBOx8JMbRXJ3F5B7um6jkKrYzWO5Z2ExFvs2EhcRp6RLnqZzKH9jciqrd3AK3mDDn1VyPT27Vmb9@erMeltNV88f3lhSvb0jqf4kuZ@@vDHmP@1g/oNk/o8b5P7DpmbvU7GgrMGwQsVEJERMydlNIcKCbn3Y7x0e7gqLM4nl22hOrudmSBVprr0r3S2zxXxxs2Ie75byRS7li2tLedwkZJF8E8HSmDyO04sGC3ckv7/4sajWlvrcrNT7UvZ@bM7XnqQiLVXX24teeVI36o2bKtgam41Sgt4z3c6naXf@oxi9k4zOLtL2hb8h8y1s6ucu16U/UoUvEMmVlo97vdy2As9wi6G8DW9b/TVgGGZiQLLOZMKpwKtZk4kL87OLW4Dt19YGLrjFa7MhWEiViesKMC4EyM1x4xIc/QIJjNu/YGlAwxWjnNwmz/yApU0Tl6u2hEzf8hoO2AdXLeMKXLjBOcp3yK1QHKv9zUCt4a6l9aWEZTMuI1v6nwuYi0fuQE6B866Fbl9tZsBTrriu1HDBcotbyEIUoZcwzew7FaoK/Y5udPEZGJCQqQpCy9ottvIJQlA/QZAHPrh1N7KMYGhh0rBJFVtHKLG6EoSbksvKFtXIUhnftldX39Dk5myhoLtrX7a2d3MlS4zLXuWGXSbvPZUZYT/cvwd9ZbhpoaEu1c0JveOExvLA4ksZRSRV@7gkTaA2NbtZJuxOThui7E86ymCuyrkfVOaxDN@6wYLpK0Tr4sSkt@73e/Cj7w855z1Hnbo6TmXWK6iTM4A2S2OY9PD4zw8WEX1LuULsLynkej9uac1MKfaZ@RzqbevwVCJynM7rNEqujaw43Gra0/Ny4BbUExItwVdxiqEhIIy4@oApqQXYAn8FtCUahElBFiAf4pIf1kwWncDseBHhvwFZf1xBXiVxmkBimK6EReItxb0iqRgBdgwonjcvV8HCoqbU0QF0h0G6isPDAiXhKWiQ49XddAakZzO1ThF451SxQUFSixoXYQoQWDRfCJAJlISXzTJoSpk0CuYv5i9RPVzBPYEpI3EE6iJ5g30scnQ2Q@6oJPgL@hBS70gIJISZ3IdYA@wzsklXoEjALFLwZEpjMmOUlsEVggEdGMDwqugXdT8@KPwYdyj3rHPktxiJypm5PAhzubcr8JW/uA45Ig4xLgZkytt@Hr72nIpLyn62V5WdqgT5rxLyCWq6yO0Q8BCTLVzRl5KLDvVrbkqC@TrmwnXjpvKPBe@Suj6Nv2YXuU1Vc2SxemDfU6jt52oybr9xIXBSocMby5f14HqqgYQxrmYokyifRbxpn/ah2hGi09X8V3Uvc5wxg/w41NfNKWNXXBfQR80g@SyBJKtnX6Zu6cuZKMJTG1Ca6tDCcxiYBbnkMyhdzMYW@/a8uWUPsrPi5HmCfF38NkLl@BknwNIRNN6iSRNqn0TnTSHqW93n0ZiLS@mKdoZXK2FWSUFJkD4xnywwg0GKhAbMufKILWA@l3kVJsdLylK8lY8HVTLVcXMwqi4C5Vd88ntBY@vklBfv5dOQvHuvlH/y/PGpLClRSugswSuLaxc5nLTI4eFkMpAEilGucy4g7KCS0h@6aqh2kFUkoxmTilWnH6pAzE8Enf/8699OOe/oKgPK83KdoQp2WWUANU3dLi3yngpCBZdWiZRyIL8q0uExpZnb6fWrQz8RvXQm/JaLRgjT4zTl1FzwqnvHgfwmC4plvtXSuc/mK5xCXsg35l6N7tjxw3Di6x7ufvvtfovst9uaDzwsaJwN9/NnNZY0/MD8HqXJcJ8LmEEnAsrWfW8Xp1BxkiLkfGiCd5K04yxB5M/H0cGwdTQjRxZh6BV40wr0K4sP9WUhGVeOUROMRxfXFOUfpMmNHsEBtHJq9Vm73YbESR6cPnxEIIXCo2MvY7g8rQ/BaWCxAd3PE@t1fukd@lUKY0UcHApyJB0NvjqulN4U6NLRV8eD8mJCBUEs7@g3XGJTVAm437kgZBvtLfRLAr989OpvT89KApfSoXFb@QlalO7NHMf58AE@9HLvw38B).

### Length 1 snippet

```
.
```

Halts instantly. In ErrLess, when the instruction pointer reaches the end of the program, it loops back to the start. This means that you have to explicitly halt your programs.

### Length 2 snippet

```
i?
```

A simple cat program that infinitely echoes stdin to stdout. `i` fetches one character of input, which is then outputted using `?`, and then the instruction pointer loops back to the start.

### Length 3 snippet

```
'A?
```

Prints the character `A` indefinitely. Why do you only need an opening quote, and not a closing quote? Simply because I thought that there is no need for a closing quote, since a character can only be, well, one character long.

### Length 4 snippet

```
12#.
```

This program does not output `12`, as one might expect, but only outputs `2`. Remember: every command is a single character long. First one is pushed to the stack, then two, then the top value of the stack is printed as a number, then the program halts.

### Length 5 snippet

```
e3*#.
```

The answer to life, the universe, and everything. This program outputs 42: `a` through `f` push 10 to 15 to the stack, and the `*` operator multiplies the top two elements of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/a-ee/w)

### Factoid

W is a simple stack-based golfing language that is surprisingly very concise. Its powerful iterator protocol and implicit input system is the cause for this.

### Length 1

```
w
```

This is in fact a valid Truth-machine program (infinite 1 while 1). Let's explain it. The first step of the execution is to prepend all of the possible inputs to the stack:

```
aaw
```

Note that the input is used both as the condition and as the body of the while loop. Therefore this program decodes to the following pseudo code:

```
while the input:
    print the input
```

The print is implicit in every while iteration. So if the input is `1` (a truthy value), this prints the input `1` indefinitely.

You might want to ask, could this code snippet produce the right result for a 0 input? Yes; the while loop returns the condition onto the stack after the execution, therefore 0 is outputted onto the stack.

**IMPORTANT NOTE.** W's while loop is only for demonstration purposes. Never use this instruction, because W is designed to allow users to use for loops over while loops.

### Length 2

```
+M
```

The W snippet that I am most proud of! It showcases more of W's powerful protocol.

So let us first try to make `'z'` (the string) as an input. The program outputs:

```
aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz
```

Well, you might be confused by this odd output. Don't worry; I will explain it.

```
aaa+M
```

This transpiles to:

```
map(a,a+a)
```

Which means double every item in the string. If the string was `'ab'` then the output would be `'aabb'`.

So, *why in the world* would it return the doubled alphabet? Well, the `M`ap instruction has an automatic range that allows users to iterate over a singleton. (Because it is pointless to do so)

In this context, this will return a range from lowercase `a` to `z`, hence the doubled alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

## [rusty_deque](https://github.com/bigyihsuan/rusty_deque/)

`rusty_deque` is a deque-based programming language that I created to learn the basics of Rust. Has a REPL and interpreter included. Each command has a "sigil" that's appended to show the side of the deque will execute on; this allows both stack-like and queue-like semantics.

### Length 1:

```
!
~
```

These are the two sigils all instructions must have appended to run in `rusty_deque`. `!` has instructions work on the left of the deque, and `~` on the right.

### Length 2:

```
1~
1!
```

Pushes a `1` onto the deque, right side or left side.

### Length 3:

```
"A"
```

Strings are not a separate type in `rusty_deque`, they are instead defined as lists of characters. Double quotes are merely syntactic sugar for strings,

### Length 4:

```
dup~
```

Most of the standard stack and queue operations are implemented; `dup` in particular will duplicate the top of the deque.

### Length 5:

```
loop!
```

There are a few control flow structures in `rusty_deque`, and `loop` is one of them. `rusty_deque` has a literal value called "blocks", which are just a bunch of instructions being treated as a value. `loop` will pop a block and endlessly execute the code inside.

### Length 6:

```
reduce~
```

There are also some functional-like list operations. `reduce` pops off a list, an accumulator, and a block to apply on each element on the list and the accumulator; `reduce` leaves the final result on the deque.

### Length 7:

```
1~3~l/!
```

`l/` is one of the instructions that operate on lists; `l/` stands for `list slice`, and takes a list, a starting index, and an ending index; it leaves a list being the elements between that range.

### Length 8:

```
[1,2,3]~
```

A list of 3 integers pushed to the right of the deque.

### Length 14:

```
{il~ol~}~loop~
```

A simple infinite cat program. Gets and prints a line forever.

Answer (score 1):

## [[min]mod](https://esolangs.org/wiki/(min)mod)

*Note: [min]mod is too difficult to use for most code challenges, and is a horrible golfing language too. Please tell me whether or not I can still keep this submission here.*

**Factoid:**

[min]mod is a language where all data is possibly nested stacks of instructions. Variables storing such stacks can themselves be executed, in which case their contents are executed element by element.

### Length 0 snippet

[Try it step by step!](https://onlinegdb.com/IOBR--qbhU) (click on the `program.[m]m` file to see the contents, and the play button to execute)

The program is stored in a sub-stack in `IS`, the built-in instruction stack; so in this case `IS` stores `[[]]`. The sub-stack is popped since it doesn't contain any instructions, and the program then terminates since `IS` is empty.

### Length 1 snippet

```
A
```

[Try it!](https://onlinegdb.com/dzwuCyaPX)

This will attempt to execute the variable `A`, and will throw an error since `A` is uninitialized.

### Length 2 snippet

```
IS
```

[Try it!](https://onlinegdb.com/DMYMAIG8J)

This is the shortest infinite loop in [min]mod, and one of the shortest valid non-empty programs.

Since the instruction stack is a variable, it can be executed like any other. In this case, the value of the instruction stack will initially be `[[IS]]`. The program will try to execute the first instruction in `IS`, which is `IS` itself, by pushing its contents onto `IS` as a new sub-stack. At principally the same time, it pops that instruction from `IS`, making `IS` now contain `[[[IS]] []]]`.

Since the first instruction in the first sub-stack in `IS` is now a stack, it will be popped. Simultaneously, its contents are pushed as a new sub-stack, making `IS` contain `[[IS] [] []]`. Now, `IS` will be executed again, grow, be executed again, grow, and so on forever (assuming the computer has infinite memory).

### Length 3 snippet

```
A..
```

[Try it!](https://onlinegdb.com/YEeoHdZfR)

Unlike the length 1 snippet, this won't throw an error since it won't actually execute `A`. The number of periods after an instruction determines its *indirection level*. An instruction or sub-stack with an indirection level of 0 will be executed, but with an indirection level of one or more, the instruction or sub-stack will instead be pushes onto the data stack, or the `DS`, which is another built-in variable.

The instruction pushed onto the data stack will have an indirection level one lower than the one executed, so `A..` pushes `A.` onto the data stack.

### Length 4 snippet

```
A.B.
```

[Try it!](https://onlinegdb.com/TniUB3OcN)

Since the program itself is a stack (or, rather, a sub-stack of the instruction stack), one might expect `B` to be pushed first, since it's presumably the top element of the stack. That's not true, however, since the program stack and its sub-stacks are reversed before being pushed onto `IS` for that exact reason: it's difficult to write code backwards. In other words, the above program pushes `A`, *then* `B`.

### Length 5 snippet

```
[].IF
```

This program first `[]` is pushed onto the data stack. Then, the built-in variable `IF` is executed. `IF` contains a special magic instruction that pops once from the data stack, then once more if the first element was an empty stack (or a variable whose value is an empty stack). Here, the stack *is* empty, but there's no elements left to pop after it's gone, so the program will throw an error.

[Try it!](https://onlinegdb.com/9KwZBMkoq)

### Length 6 snippet

```
[A].IF
```

[Try it!](https://onlinegdb.com/EGV-Ci7h0)

Unlike the length 5 snippet, the `IF` instruction here is applied to a non-empty stack, so it'll only pop once and will therefore not throw an error.

### Length 8 snippet

```
B.A.SET
```

[Try it!](https://onlinegdb.com/KeHirN3ya)

This program pushes `B` and `A` onto `DS` before executing the `SET` instruction, which sets the top element of `DS` to the second element from the top. Since both `A` and `B` are uninitialized, they'll retain their (nonexistent) values, so it would probably make more sense to set `A` to `[]` or something.

### Length 9 snippet

```
IS.UNWRAP
```

[Try it!](https://onlinegdb.com/kwcKWb4Hc)

After pushing `IS` onto `DS`, the built-in `UNWRAP` instruction will replace `IS` with a reference to its value. This means that if the current value of `IS` changes, so will the stack reference in `DS`. If `IS` is reinitialized by the `SET` instruction, however, the stack reference in `DS` will still refer to the previous value.

### Length 10 snippet

```
[].SET.SET
```

[Try it!](https://onlinegdb.com/Al9AWab-Q)

The built-in variables that makes sense to execute aren't defined as magic instructions, but rather as stacks *containing* magic instructions. Therefore, they can be given a new value like any other instruction. This program sets `SET` to an empty stack, making `SET` a noop and [min]mod Turing-incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck

Brainfuck is an esoteric programming language created in 1993 by Urban Müller. The language consists of eight commands.

Looks like there's no BF answer. Not sure why.

---

### Length 1 Snippet

```
+
```

`+` and `-` are most basic instructions to modify tape. On Modulo-256 version, `-` equals to 255 `+`.

### Length 2 Snippet

```
>>
```

Instead of cleaning up current memory, it's usually shorter to just go to a clean position

### Length 3 Snippet

```
+[]
```

An infinite loop.

### Length 4 Snippet

```
[->]
```

Decrease elements from here by one, until meeting 0.

It's useful to have unbalanced pointer moving in a loop, although that'd make it harder to understand.

### Length 5 Snippet

```
,[.,]
```

Cat. Usually first shown as it's more simple than hello world.

Moved from Length 2 since Length 5 is empty.

### Length 6 Snippet

```
[->+<]
```

Add current value to the next value.

There's no `move` or `add` in brainfuck. The only way to move value is by a loop, each time reduce source by one and increase destination.