# Source code GO!

Tags: code-golf, string, quine

Let's use augmented reality to hunt small creatures hidden in source-code. Write a quine program that outputs its own code source, except for 5 consecutive characters that will be modified and that will display a *PCG-mon* : `(^_^)`

The 5 consecutive characters can be positioned anywhere in the source code (from position `0` to `n-5`, `n` being the source code length). The source code must have a minimum length of 5 characters. The string `(^_^)` or any of its substring of length >=2 must not appear in initial source code, only in output.

Example of valid submission:

- source code `my source code`, output `my (^_^)e code`

Invalid:

- source code `(^_^) copy;`, output `(^_^) (^_^)`

### Winning criteria

The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Not to be overly negative, but this is a [generalised quine](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8595/31625) and a [do x without y](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/31625) problem. In a language with a general quining method, this is rather dull. You also haven't specified what should happen if your source code is 5 bytes or fewer.

Comment: @Fry I don't think it's possible to display the 5 characters `(^_^)` with a source code with less than 5 characters ? maybe with specific encoding...

Comment: @SuperChafouin no, but it's possible _in_ 5 characters.

Comment: While I'm not certain that it is possible in this case, it is rather trivial to create a program that prints more bytes than it contains. For example, the Pyth program `G` produces the output `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.

Comment: I'd recommend that programs should be at least 6 characters, just so nobody tries, say, [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman The line between a dull and an interesting generalised quine is rather fine. My meta answer is mostly referring to quines where the only viable solution is to obtain a string representing the entire source code and then processing that string. If there are solutions that can get away without constructing the full source code at some point, I think that usually already allows for interesting solutions (e.g. the currently leading CJam answer). As for the do X without Y, the restriction on substrings seems necessary to avoid trivial (quine) solutions.

Comment: @Sp3000 I don't think it would work, since `(^_^)` is alerady explicitly forbidden.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer `\x30\xeb\x97\xaa` (4 bytes) outputs `(^_^)` in Bubblegum

Comment: @Sp3000 Is it valid DEFLATE or LZMA 2?

Comment: @EriktheGolfer Neither - if it's not a valid compression scheme Bubblegum defaults to base 96 encoding

Comment: @Sp3000 I let you post it as an answer, although I don't think it's valid at all. You would need a filler byte, because the 5 bytes will be *modified*, not *modified or added or both*. Maybe a trailing newline would help here.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer I wasn't intending on posting it, I'm just demonstrating that Fry's initial question needs an answer.

Comment: @all added minimum source code size requirement.

Comment: @MartinEnder You're right, I spoke a bit too harshly in my comment. I think my second sentence could have been better ended with "this can be done easily". I more meant it as a warning that posts may devolve into generalised quines with basic restricted source workarounds.

Answer (score 13):

## Javascript ES6, 44 bytes

```
$=_=>`$=(\^\_\^\)${($+'').slice(5)};$()`;$()
```

Output:

```
$=(^_^)=(\^\_\^\)${($+'').slice(5)};$()`;$()
```

Still working on golfing, but it works for now.

Comment: +1 for having another face: `=_=`

Comment: Can't you do `$=_=>\`(\^\_\^\)${($+'').slice(3)};$()\`;$()` (it actually looks even nicer because now it looks like you're waking up a sleeping face). :)

Answer (score 10):

## Vim, <s>33</s>, 27 keystrokes

```
qqqqqS(<C-v>94_<C-v>94)q@q<esc>hh"qPq@q
```

Note that `<C-v>` means ctrl+v, and is byte `0x16` and `<esc>` is the escape character, and is byte `0x1B`.

This just uses a slightly modified version of my [Golf you a quine for great good!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92774/31716) answer.

Outputs:

```
(^_^)S(^V94_^V94)q@q^[hh"qPq@q
```

This is valid since `^V` is the way vim represents `<C-v>` and `^[` is the way vim represents `<esc>`.

The basic idea, is just to input the text `(^_^)` by its code points so we can avoid putting those characters in the source code. In insert mode, `<C-v>number` will insert the ASCII character of "number". However, since the challenge says:

> The string `(^_^)` or any of its substring of length >=2 must not appear in initial source code, only in output.

This answer abuses the "substring" rule by only entering the codepoints of the `^` characters, and entering `(`, `_`, and `)` directly.

Here's a gif that lets you see this solution in action, and puts the source code and output side by side for comparison:

[image]

Comment: pretty sneaky, using the `^` control char... +1

Answer (score 7):

### [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
"(_)"
_p'^*
```

[Online interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22(_)%22%0A_p'%5E*) *(-2 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder)*.

```
"(_)"             Push string
      _p          Duplicate and print repr with newline
        '^*       Join string with '^'
```

Answer (score 3):

### CJAM, <strike>16</strike> 15 bytes

Try it [here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B%22%5E(_)%22(*%7D_~sss).

```
{"^(_)"(*}_~sss
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>115</s> <s>111</s> 107 bytes

```
def f():s='def f():s=%r;print s%%s.replace(s[:5],"^".join("(_)"))';print s%s.replace(s[:5],"^".join("(_)"))
```

Call `f()` and the output is:

```
def f():s='(^_^)():s=%r;print s%%s.replace(s[:5],"^".join("(_)"))';print s%s.replace(s[:5],"^".join("(_)"))
```

Inspired in part by [this answer to a similar question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44925).

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 91 bytes

There's already a JavaScript answer, but there's not a non-source-reading JS answer:

```
a="a=%s;co%s.log(a,uneval(a),`(${'^'}_${'^'})`)";console.log(a,uneval(a),`(${'^'}_${'^'})`)
```

This is based on my non-source-reading answer to [Golf you a quine for great good!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92449/42545). Outputs

```
a="a=%s;co%s.log(a,uneval(a),`(${'^'}_${'^'})`)";co(^_^).log(a,uneval(a),`(${'^'}_${'^'})`)
```

This can easily be modified by moving around the second `%s` in the string. For example,

```
a="a=%s;console.log(a,uneval(a),`($%s_${'^'})`)";console.log(a,uneval(a),`(${'^'}_${'^'})`)
```

outputs

```
a="a=%s;console.log(a,uneval(a),`($%s_${'^'})`)";console.log(a,uneval(a),`($(^_^)_${'^'})`)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Go (golang), 131 bytes

This challenge must have an answer in Go!

```
package main;import"fmt";func main(){a:="package main;import\"fmt\";func(%c_%[1]c)(){a:=%q;fmt.Printf(a,94,a)}";fmt.Printf(a,94,a)}
```

[Try it online!](https://play.golang.org/p/5900Og5Etr)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“4094959441b³ỌØV”ṘVabc
```

Available at **[TryItOnline](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcNDA5NDk1OTQ0MWLCs-G7jMOYVuKAneG5mFZhYmM&input=)**

Uses the built-in [payload capable](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4924/53748) quine `“ØV”ṘV`
The `abc` on the end is just filler to be replaced
`b³` converts the integer into base 100, resulting in `[40,94,95,94,41]`
`Ọ` casts to characters, resulting in `(^_^)`
So the whole result is `“4094959441b³ỌØV”(^_^)`

Answer (score 2):

## C# 5.0, 715 bytes

I know, this is huge. Just wanted to add a C# solution.

```
/*^()_*/using System.CodeDom;namespace System{class P{static void Main(){var b="/*^()_*/using System.CodeDom;namespace System{{class P{{static void Main(){{var b={0};var f=new string(new[]{{b[3],b[2],b[5],b[2],b[4]}});var w=new IO.StringWriter();CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider(\"CSharp\").GenerateCodeFromExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(b),w,null);Console.WriteLine(b.Replace(\"[4]}}}}}}}}\",f),w);Console.ReadKey();}}}}}}";var f=new string(new[]{b[3],b[2],b[5],b[2],b[4]});var w=new IO.StringWriter();CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp").GenerateCodeFromExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(b),w,null);Console.WriteLine(b.Replace("[4]}}}}",f),w);Console.ReadKey();}}}
```

The output is:

```
/*^()_*/using System.CodeDom;namespace System{class P{static void Main(){var b="/*^()_*/using System.CodeDom;namespace System{{class P{{static void Main(){{var b={0};var f=new string(new[]{{b[3],b[2],b[5],b[2],b[4]}});var w=new IO.StringWriter();CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider(\"CSharp\").GenerateCodeFromExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(b),w,null);Console.WriteLine(b.Replace(\"[4]}}}}}}}}\",f),w);Console.ReadKey();}}}}}}";var f=new string(new[]{b[3],b[2],b[5],b[2],b[4]});var w=new IO.StringWriter();CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp").GenerateCodeFromExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(b),w,null);Console.WriteLine(b.Replace("(^_^)}}",f),w);Console.ReadKey();}}}
```

Available [at Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/nj0xwb)

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 178 bytes

```
Q='#(8_8)
printf "Q=\47"
echo -n "$Q"|sed -r "s~(_|\()8~\1^~g"
echo -e "\x27"
tail<<<"$Q" -n4'
printf "Q=\47"
echo -n "$Q"|sed -r "s~(_|\()8~\1^~g"
echo -e "\x27"
tail<<<"$Q" -n4
```

Pfff, I am not good at quines :/ Any suggestion to golf it more is more than welcome! :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
')_`_*i't&Dwqh
```

Produces the output `` ')_`_*i'(^_^)h ``.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=JylfYF8qaSd0JkR3cWg&input=)

#### Explanation

```
')_`_*i'  % Push this string
t&D       % Duplicate and get string representation (i.e. enclose with quotes)
w         % Swap
q         % Subtract 1. Transforms ')_`_*i' into the code points of '(^_^)h'
h         % Concatenate. Automatically casts code points to chars. Implicitly display
```

Comment: My first attempt at a quine!