# Fizz Buzz.. Crackle Pop! (Generalized Fizz Buzz)

Tags: code-golf, fizzbuzz

We've all heard of the ol' Fizz Buzz problem, but what happens when you try to apply it with more factors? Fizz Buzz Crackle Pop!

## The Challenge

Write a **full program** that takes an *integer* input **n**, then n tuples containing an integer and a string, then another integer (>1) k, as such:

```
 n int1 str1 int2 str2 (...) intn strn k
```

You can take this line from either command line or STDIN.

Then, for all integers 1 to k, if it is divisible by any of *int1*, *int2*...*intn*, output all corresponding *str*s in the input order, followed by a newline. If it isn't, then just output the integer, followed by a newline.

For example, with input

```
3 2 Fizz 3 Buzz 5 Crackle 10
```

we get

```
1
Fizz
Buzz
Fizz
Crackle
FizzBuzz
7
Fizz
Buzz
FizzCrackle
```

But with input (notice the order change)

```
3 3 Buzz 2 Fizz 5 Crackle 10
```

we get

```
1
Fizz
Buzz
Fizz
Crackle
BuzzFizz
7
Fizz
Buzz
FizzCrackle
```

Optional trailing newline is acceptable.

Shortest code in bytes wins.

## Edits:

Obviously I've missed out a lot, sorry.

- Inputs from <strike>console and STDIN, anything else gets +5 bytes (:c)</strike> anywhere
- Full programs please.
- Assume non-empty strings for strs
- No guarantees for uniqueness of ints

Sample C++ program (limited at 20 because I'm lazy):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string names[20];
  int mods[20], n, max;
  cin >> max >> n;
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    cin >> mods[i] >> names[i];
  }
  for (int i=1; i<=max; i++) {
    bool found = false;

    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
      if (i % mods[j] == 0) {
        found = true;
        cout << names[j];
      }
    }
    if (!found)
     cout << i;
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47330/8478)

Comment: Does the input need to be so rigid? Or could we take in a hashtable/dictionary/array/etc. in language's native format?

Comment: Also, welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Is a leading newline acceptable?

Comment: What if two of the numbers are the same? Will they always be unique positive integers?

Comment: What guarantees are there about the numbers: will they all be positive, or at least non-zero? What about the strings: are they all non-empty?

Comment: Also: can we submit a function rather than a full program? I'm voting to close as _unclear what you're asking_ until these points are clarified, and before there are too many answers which may turn out to be invalid.

Comment: @Arnauld That's the default.

Comment: A better title might be `Generalized Fizz Buzz`.

Comment: @mbomb007 True. But the way the question is written, it seems like the OP is expecting a program exclusively (_"write a program"_ and _"you can take this line from either command line or STDIN"_)

Comment: Should functions become allowed, someone please ping me unless @Arnauld has meanwhile saved 12 bytes on his answer.

Comment: @MartinEnder Kinda related, but more general than just 3.

Comment: Would it be too late to add bonus marks? ;))

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Voted to reopen. The default rules however are to accept either a program or a function, and it is usually encouraged to be quite flexible on the input format (and, maybe to a lesser extent, the output format). So please consider this for your future challenges. (Also, I think you should remove the _anything else gets +5 bytes_ rule. It should be either allowed or not.)

Comment: @Arnauld I guess I'll allow it.

Comment: May the input be in a different order than specified, i.e. `strn intn` rather than `intn strn`?

Comment: @R.Kap No it can't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 28 bytes

```
#¦¤U¨2ôøVXLvY`sysÖÏJDg1‹iy},
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@698aNmhJaGHVhgd3nJ4R1iET1lkQnFl8eFph/u9XNINHzXszKys1fn/31jBWMGptKpKwUjBLRNImSo4FyUmZ@ekKhgaAAA)

**Or with a different input format:**

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

```
Lv²y³ÖÏJDg1‹iy},
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@9TdmhT5aHNh6cd7vdySTd81LAzs7JW5/9/QwOuaHWn0qoqdR11t0ww5VyUmJydk6oeyxVtrGOkYxoLAA)

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 90 bytes

Generates a leading newline.

```js
f=(a,i=a.pop())=>i?f(a,i-1)+`
`+(a.map((_,j)=>++j>a[0]|i%a[j*2-1]?'':a[j*2]).join``||i):''
```

#### Test

```js
f=(a,i=a.pop())=>i?f(a,i-1)+`
`+(a.map((_,j)=>++j>a[0]|i%a[j*2-1]?'':a[j*2]).join``||i):''

console.log(f([3, 2, 'Fizz', 3, 'Buzz', 5, 'Crackle', 10]))
console.log(f([3, 3, 'Buzz', 2, 'Fizz', 5, 'Crackle', 10]))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 98 bytes

```python
lambda b:[''.join(''if x%b[1+i*2]else b[2+i*2]for i in range(b[0]))or`x`for x in range(1,b[-1]+1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#RcnRCsIgFIDhVzk3cbRZTKOboJuCXsKEaWmcWm7YBmMvb7ab7v6PPxyvubVvd7fgDhpx@@woMkQKMK2clhWtlfHtx4PTakHoEhBQhGTjwzOna8N5l5qp@Z3pf6RweiNNJbnJfaI4sMAo9uPAOOdZ7wQoAXiheUYBRXgal9yXPCd7e7W@SNbmCw)

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 194 bytes

```
#include <iostream>
#define p std::cout<<
int main(int c,char**a){c=2*atoi(a[1])+2;int x,f,i,n=atoi(a[c]);for(x=1;x<=n;x++){f=0;for(i=2;i<c;i+=2)if(x%atoi(a[i])<1)f=1,p a[i+1];if(!f)p x;p'\n';}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int c, char **a) {
    c = 2 * atoi(a[1]) + 2;
    int x, f, i, n = atoi(a[c]);
    for (x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
        f = 0;
        for (i = 2; i < c; i += 2)
            if (x % atoi(a[i]) < 1) f = 1, std::cout << a[i+1];
        if (!f) std::cout << x;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: If the result of `x%atoi(a[i])` can't be negative, then just check `x%atoi(a[i])<1`.

Comment: @TuukkaX Good point, thanks.

Comment: Also, I'm quite sure you can do `p'\n'` :)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 99 bytes

Based on [primo´s FizzBuzz answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58674/55735): `õ` is chr(245), a bit inverted newline.

```php
for(;$i++<($a=$argv)[$z=$argc-1];){for($k=$s="";$z>$k+=2;)$s.=[$a[$k+1]][$i%$a[$k]];echo$s?:$i,~õ;}
```

ignores the first argument; run with `-nr`.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>105</s> 97 bytes

```
g=(m,k,i=1)=>i<-~k?([...m.keys()].filter(j=>i%j<1).map(j=>m.get(j)).join``||i)+"\n"+g(m,k,i+1):""
```

Takes in a map of pairs **m** (integer, string) and an integer **k**. Comes with a trailing newline.

Here's a non-recursive version (105 bytes), but doesn't yield a trailing newline.

```
m=>k=>[...Array(k).keys()].map(x=>[...m.keys()].filter(j=>-~x%j<1).map(j=>m.get(j)).join``||x+1).join`\n`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#dczNCoJAGIXhfVchA8F8OH00RZvSgoJ2XcEkKDIN4/wYakQi3boZtRFq@XI4T69i6phhOuYQb3U0e5odFYjo0MhHTSHBi7aNrGgxzNMi4oAuu77LoZINLQCwKLVP067TEJKzJ6H6kCGHNSF9Xvq6tBJtqaiiXt6D0wAIsWABOeq2JQkLxHKI/e0bqyEOVZYbK0mSAAv4HGAz@QeNviP1N9S/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 331 bytes

Because Java.

```
import java.util.*;class A{A(int c,String x){i=c;v=x;}int i;String v;void x(String[]x){ArrayList<A>l=new ArrayList();int n=0;for(;++n<x.length-1;)l.add(new A(Integer.valueOf(x[n++]),x[n]));n=Integer.valueOf(x[n]);for(int i=1;i++<n;){String o="";boolean y=1>0;for(A a:l)if(i%a.i==0){y=1<0;o+=a.v;}if(y)o+=i;System.out.println(o);}}}
```

This is the full class required for this. However, in order to run it, you must call the method `x` on an existing instance of `A`. For the sake of testing, I have provided a command-line runnable class below, which is partially ungolfed.

```
import java.util.*;
class A{
A(int c,String x){i=c;v=x;}
int i;
String v;
void x(String[]x){
ArrayList<A>l=new ArrayList();
int n=0;
for(;++n<x.length-1;)
l.add(new A(Integer.valueOf(x[n++]),x[n]));
n=Integer.valueOf(x[n]);
for(int i=1;i++<n;){
String o="";
boolean y=1>0;
for(A a:l)if(i%a.i==0){y=1<0;o+=a.v;}
if(y)o+=i;
System.out.println(o);
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
new A(0,"").x(args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 85 bytes

```
args rev...2*nsgroup rev 2 chunk@s~>{!s[1#]map s[0#n|]map keep''join:[n]\¬if out}map
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/stacked#@59YlF6sUJRapqenZ6SVV5xelF9aAOIrGCkkZ5TmZTsU19lVKxZHGyrH5iYWKBRHGyjn1YCZ2ampBerqWfmZeVbRebExh9Zkpinkl5bUAuX@//9v/N/ov5tnVBSQ4RQKpEz/Owc5Onv7uP43NAAA) Alternatively, 86 bytes:

```
args behead...@k sgroup 2 chunk@s k~>{!s[1#]map s[0#n|]map keep''join:[n]\¬if out}map
```

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 121 bytes

```
?dstsw?[rdlt:Y:Rlt1-dst0<q]dsqx?sb1sm[ln;Y;RnlP1+sP]ss[lmn]sF[1sn0sP[lnd;Ylmr%0=s1+dsnlw!<g]dsgxlP0=Flm1+dsm10Plb!<i]dsix
```

Takes input on 3 separate lines, the first line containing the integer `n`, the second housing the `int str` tuples with the strings enclosed in square brackets (`[]`), and the third line consists of the integer `k`. For example, `3 2 Fizz 3 Buzz 5 Crackle 10` could be input as:

```
3
3 [Buzz] 2 [Fizz] 5 [Crackle]
10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#FYw9C4MwFAB3f0UcOkkhr9LFDwItOAe38MhQmyLSl4B5FsU/b@N23MEdyvHCq8LoaKlM1dMC16RkM1vH86Z4APZIoTZ1H0hDwdoyI/lguUPgIFmn7GpDPl5ky1A4DrTmzZgG40Zath3503qQmoa8mVKYtuMos1Lg47fvVtwEdtMJd4HP@Hp/6WMzkH8)

#### Or taking input in a different order:

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 118 bytes

```
?dstsw[dlt:Y:Rlt1-dst0<q]dsqxsb1sm[ln;Y;RnlP1+sP]ss[lmn]sF[1sn0sP[lnd;Ylmr%0=s1+dsnlw!<g]dsgxlP0=Flm1+dsm10Plb!<i]dsix
```

This takes input in a different order, but on a single line in the format

```
k [str1] int1 [str2] int2 (...) [strn] intn n
```

For example, `3 2 Fizz 3 Buzz 5 Crackle 10` would be input as:

```
10 [Buzz] 3 [Fizz] 2 [Crackle] 5 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#Fcs9C4MwFIXhvxKHTlLIbeniB4UWnINbuGSoTRHpTUCPRfHP27gdnpez3z1mLOxlLmzRykznBLoance4oiMElljaso1iKIdxAEuIDg0TooZJ2ZdWwnTSNSj3iLJkVZ/@/SpG142EQwNpI11WDSkM676TVvz4bZtTV8XNcIyL4uf0en/l49Qt8R8)