# Nesting list with a value repeated `n` amount of times

Tags: code-golf, array, recursion

Given the input of `n` and `value`. The code is supposed to nest the single element list with `value` repeated `n` times. The final output should be a multilevel nested list with single repeated values in all sublists.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

### Test cases:

```
n = 1, value = 'a': ['a']
n = 2, value = 'a': ['a', ['a']]
n = 3, value = 'a': ['a', ['a', ['a']]]
n = 4, value = 'a': ['a', ['a', ['a', ['a']]]]
n = 5, value = 'a': ['a', ['a', ['a', ['a', ['a']]]]]
n = 6, value = 'a': ['a', ['a', ['a', ['a', ['a', ['a']]]]]]
```

Comment: Is `n` always greater than zero? If so, can we take `n` 0-indexed?

Comment: Do we need to include the commas in the output?  And can the value be input as a string?

Comment: @theorist Just a sequence is enough, in any way

Comment: @att Yes. Always bigger than `0`

Comment: Can we output {{{{{{a}, a}, a}, a}, a}, a} ?

Comment: @ZaMoC Sure....

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47351/16766)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
F‚Ù
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f7VHDrMMz//8340oEAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
F     # Loop the first input amount of times:
 ‚    #  Pair the (implicit) second input-value with the current list
  Ù   #  And uniquify it (which only does something in the first iteration,
      #  transforming the pair of values to a single wrapped value)
      # (after the loop, the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: 3 bytes! So far I think you're the winner.

Answer (score 20):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>33</s> 30 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to @xnor*

```python
lambda n,v:eval('[v,'*n+']'*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYtBCoMwEEX3nuJvwiQ6m7opBDyJ7WKKiRXsKMEGevqYRUs3D/7jv/1zPDftSxxuZZXXYxIoZx@yrJbGzNRqR/dKV6p6BwwgoSZuCYpFkUTnYC@Mq/MN9rToAdL6MhPjV5jkCQZWv8ox4n@UEw)

Comment: Wow! Good thought!!

Comment: It looks like you can just do `lambda n,v:eval('[v,'*n+']'*n)`

Comment: @xnor Haha! I honestly have no idea how I didn't see that...

Comment: Even cooler now!

Answer (score 8):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 34 bytes

```
f=lambda x,n:n and[x,f(x,n-1)][:n]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3ldJscxJzk1ISFSp08qzyFBLzUqIrdNI0gDxdQ83YaKu8WKhK3bT8IoUshcw8haLEvPRUDXNNKy4FICgoyswr0UjTSM4o0jAz0c7S1FHI0tSEaIJZAwA)

Thanks to loopy walt for this one.

---

Old answers:

### [Python](https://www.python.org), 36 bytes

```
f=lambda x,n:[x][n>1:]or[x,f(x,n-1)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3VdJscxJzk1ISFSp08qyiK2Kj8-wMrWLzi6IrdNI0gGK6hpqxELUbCooy80o00jSUEpV0FEw1NSHCMKMA)

### [Python](https://www.python.org), <sup><s>36</s></sup> 35 bytes

```
f=lambda x,n:n*[1]and[[x]+f(x,n-1)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3ldNscxJzk1ISFSp08qzytKINYxPzUqKjK2K10zSAQrqGmrEQpZsLijLzSjTSNJQSlXQUTDWjDWI1ITIwwwA)

[Outputs as a singleton list](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11884), but that feels like cheating here.

### [Python](https://www.python.org), 39 bytes

```
f=lambda x,n:[x]+(~-n*[1]and[f(x,n-1)])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY31dNscxJzk1ISFSp08qyiK2K1Nep087SiDWMT81Ki0zSAorqGmrGaEOUbCooy80o00jSUEpV0FEw1ocIw0wA)

### [Python](https://www.python.org), 37 bytes

```
f=lambda x,n:x+(~-n*[1]and[f(x,n-1)])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3VdNscxJzk1ISFSp08qwqtDXqdPO0og1jE_NSotM0gGK6hpqxmhDFmwqKMvNKNNI0opUSlWJ1FEw1oRIw0wA)

Inputs as a singleton list.

Comment: Wow! Very clever!

Comment: You can go zero-based and save two bytes in the topmost lambda (dropping `>1`).

Comment: @loopywalt that's not how I interpret OP's reply to @​att's comment

Comment: Well, they don't say no, do they? How about this `f=lambda x,n:[x,n<2or f(x,n-1)][:n]`, then (35 bytes)? https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3ldNscxJzk1ISFSp08qyigYSNUX6RQpoGkKVrqBkbbZUXC1WqmwaUyFLIzFMoSsxLT9Uw17TiUgCCgqLMvBKNNI3kjCINMxPtLE0dhSxNTYgmmD0A

Comment: 34 if you are ok with requiring n>0. https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3ldJscxJzk1ISFSp08qzyFBLzUqIrdNI0gDxdQ83YaKu8WKhK3bT8IoUshcw8haLEvPRUDXNNKy4FICgoyswr0UjTSM4o0jAz0c7S1FHI0tSEaIJZAwA And I'm not dingledooper :-)

Comment: @loopywalt sorry, your avatars are too similar ;)

Answer (score 8):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 4 bytes

```
(⁰"U
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJyIiwiIiwiKOKBsFwiVSIsIiIsIjNcbjIiXQ==)

The joys of golfing language :)

### Explained

```
(⁰"U
(     # n times:
 ⁰    #   push the value
  "U  #   pair and uniquify - a port of the 05ab1e answer
```

Comment: Wow... 4 bytes!!

Comment: That's so short...  how-

Answer (score 7):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 25 bytes

```
n=>v=>((a=>[v,a])*n)([v])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@z/P1q7M1k5DI9HWLrpMJzFWUytPUyO6LFbzf0FRZl6JRpqGmaaGoabmfwA)

```
n=>v=>((a=>[v,a])*n)([v])    This language is stupid
n=>                          Given n
  v=>                        and v
       (a=>[v,a])            pair v with the current accumulator
                 *n          n times
      (            )([v])    and call that on [v]
```

Comment: Thanks, very cool. "this language" is stupid lol

Comment: @U12-F̉͋̅̾̇orward yep - I made this language, so I know better than anyone just how stupid it is :P

Comment: Wow! Really! Very interesting. Cool.

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), <s>30</s> 21 bytes

```
Print[""@@#~Nest~##]&
```

-9 bytes from @att!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P6AoM68kWknJwUG5zi@1uKROWTlW7X@ag4Nrcka@g7JaXXByYl5dNVd1oo5hrQ6IMgJRhuY6xhCuCYQyBYsa6RnrmNVy1f4HAA)

Sample I/O:

```
Print[""@@#~Nest~##]&@@{a,3}
```

> [a[a[a]]]

```
Print[""@@#~Nest~##]&@@{17,3}
```

> [17[17[17]]]

```
Print[""@@#~Nest~##]&@@{Pi,6}
```

> \$[\pi [\pi [\pi [\pi [\pi [\pi ]]]]]]\$

Comment: Is a separator not needed? [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P6AoM68kWknJwUG5zi@1uKROWTlW7X@ag4Nrcka@g7JaXXByYl5dNVe1UqKSjmGtDoRhBGMYwxgmMIYpjGFWy1X7HwA) if so, or [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P6AoM68kWknJwcEvtbgkWtnGTklHSUdZOTZW7X@ag4Nrcka@g7JaXXByYl5dNVe1UqKSjmGtDoRhBGMYwxgmMIYpjGFWy1X7HwA) if it is.

Comment: (with separator only works if `value` is a string)

Answer (score 6):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 9 bytes

```
∾⟜⋈´⥊⟜⋈⟜⋈
```

*<sup>Pins and bowties FTW</sup>*

Anonymous tacit function that takes two arguments and returns a nested list. [This](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/doc/arrayrepr.html#simple-lists) is why the list formatting looks weird. [Run it online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oi+4p+c4ouIwrTipYrin5zii4jin5zii4gKCjUgRiAiYSI=)

#### Explanation

The left argument is the count; the right argument is the value. The example uses a left argument of `2` and a right argument of `0`.

```
∾⟜⋈´⥊⟜⋈⟜⋈
          ⟜⋈  Wrap the right argument in a list: ⟨ 0 ⟩, and then
       ⟜⋈     Wrap that list in a list: ⟨ ⟨ 0 ⟩ ⟩, and then
     ⥊        Reshape to a length equaling the left argument: ⟨ ⟨ 0 ⟩ ⟨ 0 ⟩ ⟩
    ´          Right-fold that list on this function:
 ⟜⋈             Wrap the right argument in a list: ⟨ ⟨ 0 ⟩ ⟩, and then
∾                Concatenate with the left argument: ⟨ 0 ⟩ ∾ ⟨ ⟨ 0 ⟩ ⟩ → ⟨ 0 ⟨ 0 ⟩ ⟩
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 46 bytes

```r
function(n,v)Reduce(list,rep(v,n-1),list(v),T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY6xDsIwDETn9iuiLNiSQWJhgf4EYisdUHEgUhRCklZCiG8vJBSQYGHz@e6e7QclVtNBdbaN@mTBUo9r3nctg9EhkmcHPdnpHClp6JE2ODjPMV6c1zambeWqN8DgtSzaXQRZSywLdfKghbYi8PnhJbPQCnSYZZypa900iO41CTaBRe5vpaTnlvIc2FUyMTNgZdge4jExc5qScxtPNw9xK0P0oGBOk90EsXwyrcTl1/efzHLMpNTYXvzRXvy2hzs)

Non-recursive approach. Pretty-printing and test harness taken from [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239892/67312) who insisted I post this as my own.

Comment: Nice; and based on the OP's reply to ZaMoC's comment/question, you can probably leave-out the ```,T``` to save 2 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
+J',R¹e'[²R']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X9tLXSfo0M5U9ehDm4LUY////6@eqP7fDAA)

Not an ideal challenge for a language that doesn't support ragged lists...

```
+              # join together:
    R¹         #  arg1 repeats of
      e        #   2-element list of
       '[      #    '[' and
         ²     #    arg2,
 J',           #  joined by commas,
               #  and
     R']       #  arg1 repeats of ']'
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
W{Ɱṭ/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z@8@tHGdQ93rtX/f3i5g/7RSQ93ztCM/P8/2lDHIFYn2ghMGoNJEzBpCibNgCQA)

Value on left, \$n\$ on right

```
W        The value wrapped in a singleton list
 {Ɱ      for each 1..n.
   ṭ/    Reduce by Funky Reverse Append™.
```

Comment: Just curious, how do you type those characters? :)

Comment: @U12-F̉͋̅̾̇orward https://abrudz.github.io/lb/jelly

Comment: Wow!.... Interesting

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>29</s> 23 bytes

```ruby
->n,a{eval'[a,'*n+?]*n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5PJ7E6tSwxRz06UUddK0/bPlYrr/Z/gUJatLGOfWLsfwA)

Stole the eval trick from dingledooper

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 49 bytes

```r
f=function(n,v)`if`(n-1,list(v,f(n-1,v)),list(v))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY5LCoMwEIbX5hQhGzOQFty4sZ7ECook7UBI0yQVSvHs1kSL0G66m/kf34ybZ1WrhxkC3gw3YoQOVcfNoRAafeCjUGkZATYBYLZOhvC0Dk2IWm13goYXyYY@cNYwIJm6OY4UDfXyvnjRzFBx9McE002DbQtgPxOV2kua@mfGxKqKNHtpaxaZCXDS0lzCNTJTWkRn2k63yzIRHxxXvBB5nwOQlWkYVF/f75lqy8TU1i7/aJe/7fkN)

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##jY6xDsIwDETn9iuiLNiSQWJhgf4EYisdUHEgUhRCklZCiG8vJBSQYGHz@e6e7QclVtNBdbaN@mTBUo9r3nctg9EhkmcHPdnpHClp6JE2ODjPMV6c1zambeWqN8DgtSzaXQRZSywLdfKghbYi8PnhJbPQCnSYZZypa900iO41CTaBRe5vpaTnlvIc2FUyMTNgZdge4jExc5qScxtPNw9xK0P0oGBOk90EsXwyrcTl1/efzHLMpNTYXvzRXvy2hzs)

Comment: @Giuseppe - that's a different answer.  Post it.

Comment: [If you insist!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239914/67312)

Answer (score 5):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 49 bytes

```racket
(define(f x n)(if(= n 1)`(,x)`(,x,(f x(- n 1)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pMzk4t@a@ck5iXrlAE4WikpKZl5qVqpClUKORpamSmadgq5CkYaiZo6FSACR2QlIYuWBAEgDoyiwtyEisVgBLqFQrmQCEA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 24 bytes

```
t&@Do[t={#,t},Set@t;#2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7v0TNwSU/usS2WlmnpFYnOLXEocRa2ShW7X9AUWZeSbSyrl1IfnAJkJ0enebgoKzjmVdQWuKWX5QbG6tWF5ycmFdXzVWtlKikY1irA2EYwRjGMIYJjGEKY5jVctX@BwA)

Input `[n, value]`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 24 bytes

0-indexed

```
Fold[List,{#},Table@##]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773y0/JyXaJ7O4RKdauVYnJDEpJ9VBWTlW7X9AUWZeiYJDerRSopKOoUHs//8A)

Comment: The order is reversed.

Comment: @att I guess we will wait for OP to decide...

Comment: The challenge specification clearly shows which order it should be in, which was OP's decision when they made the challenge in the first place.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino OP says my answer is valid. Please check the main comments

Answer (score 4):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
a*Åαç
```

Outputs reversed (e.g. `[[["a"],"a"],"a"]` instead of `["a",["a",["a"]]]`), which is allowed based on the comments under the challenge.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z9R63DruY2Hl///r5SYlKykYMqllKikYAYA)

**Explanation:**

```python
a      # Wrap the (implicit) input-string into a list
       #  e.g. "abc" → ["abc"]
 *     # Repeat it the (implicit) input-integer amount of times
       #  e.g. 5 → ["abc","abc","abc","abc","abc"]
  Å    # For-each over these strings,
       # using the following 2 characters as inner code-block:
   α   #  Wrap the top two values into a list
       #  (which will wrap with the implicit loop-index 0 in the first iteration)
       #   e.g. [0,"abc"] in the first iteration
       #        [["abc"],"abc"] in the second iteration
       #        [[["abc"],"abc"],"abc"] in the third, etc.
    ç  #  Remove all 0s from the list with a falsey filter
       #  (only relevant for the first iteration: [0,"abc"] → ["abc"])
       # (after the loop, the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 4):

## APL+WIN, 28 bytes

Prompts for n followed by value

```
(¯1↓∊n⍴⊂'[',⎕,','),(n←⎕)⍴']'
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv8ah9YaP2iY/6ujKe9S75VFXk3q0ug5QjY66jrqmjkYeUCWQpwmUU49V/w/UwvU/jcuMS11dPRGIAQ)

Comment: From the image it looks as if the outermost list (=box?) doesn't contain an 'a' alement...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks for picking that up. I could not find an easy fix so went with a new approach

Comment: Hmm... don't you now have an unwanted comma in the innermost list...?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks again. Fixed. Old age seems to be getting the better of me ;(

Answer (score 4):

## [HBL](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
1,(?(-.)(1('?(-.),)?)?
```

[Try it!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/hbl/?f=0&p=MSwoPygtLikoMSgnPygtLiksKT8pPw__&a=NQo0Mg__)

#### Explanation

A recursive function:

```
1,(?(-.)(1('?(-.),)?)?
1                       Cons
 ,                      the second argument with:
  (?(-.)                 If the first argument decremented is truthy (> 1):
        (1          )     Cons
          ('?     )        Recursive call with
             (-.)           First argument decremented
                 ,          Second argument unchanged
                   ?      with nil (empty list)
                         Else (the first argument is 1):
                     ?    Nil (empty list)
```

I.e., if the first argument is 1, we get `(cons arg2 nil)`, which simply creates a singleton list containing the second argument; and if the first argument is greater than 1, we get `(cons arg2 (cons [recursive-call] nil))`, which wraps the result of the recursive call in a singleton list and then prepends the second argument to it.

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>56</s> 55 bytes

```php
function($n,$a){for($r=[$a];--$n;)$r=[$a,$r];return$r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcexCoMwEAbgPU@R4QcTiKPTVXyQIuXQBjt4HofpIn326@C3fbqpPybdNKCOXpss5@eQBCngfNXDEmx8gmfqewjlewU2k73PZgKjn1MIX7bX2nZNETUNJXbc5ZjJfXD@Aw)

Like often, PHP makes the worst score, akin only to C, but dirtier and with lots of $

EDIT: -1 byte, these dollars allow us some trickery with the parser after all

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) 50 bytes

```php
function f($c,$n){return --$n?[$c,f($c,$n)]:[$c];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MU0jRUknVU8jSri1JLSovyFHR1VfLso4FiMIlYKyAv1rr2v3VBUWZeSXyRRpqGeqK6joKxpqb1fwA)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 24 bytes

*-2 thanks to @tsh*

```
n=>g=x=>--x?[n,g(x)]:[n]
```

Comment: Why not `--x` instead.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 41 bytes

```powershell
$n,$a=$args
1..$n|%{$r=$a,@($r)|?{$_}}
$r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lcqxCsIwEADQPV9xw2kVmmK0uhWFOjm7S5CrHWoSLkWHJN8exS8w6@M5@yb2I02TvFumjEMXMpoadYeaH16opkETFwH5C/VphbyOx4C3lARyTkIscQAFla4gQm/Ni3i@Wnnx1oDs7dMxeQ/yTG4eQW1@fVvWd2W9Lev7sn74v@cP)

Please note that this does not work for n = 1, for some reason PowerShell treats it as a string. Even when forcing to return an array.

Let me know if not OK and I'll withdraw this answer!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's ok! doesn't matter much

Comment: Or you could add an extra code for an if else for whether `n` is 1. Then just return the value in a singular list

Comment: I tried but PowerShell doesn't want it:
[With an explicit .Net list for example](https://tio.run/##HcvBCoJAEIDh@z7FHqZUcJe8ClFhp4gudYuIRcYU1h2ZXRJRn92k68/3d9Qj@xqtVSUxLlDtxwVcCmYPhj9eZFqDmzYj8BrSYwycTIcR3vMsxPM@@ICtLshaLENDzusTsxmujQ@vPL9hH/@PZFn1FiqZychEcpIFuS9yeJC6eHJSFdR2jN5LdcYu1DLbieUH "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 29 bytes

```
f(a,n)=if(n--,[a,f(a,n)],[a])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYqxCoAwDAV/5eGUQDI4dKw/Ih26VLrEEvz/GHE5juNW96nXihjUxbjOQaYqZ5c/tNTGMW4nQ8UuKILl0x7KB9awQY/Et8OYOV4)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
ＦＮ≔⟦⁺⟦η⟧υ⟧υ⭆¹⊟υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NTwbG4ODM9TyM6IKe0WCM6I1ZHoVQTTFhzBRRl5pVoBJcAqXTfxAINQx2FgPwCjVJNTU3r//@jzXQU1BPVY//rluUAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＮ
```

Repeat `n` times...

```
≔⟦⁺⟦η⟧υ⟧υ
```

... prepend `value` to the initially predefined empty list, then wrap that in another list.

```
⭆¹⊟υ
```

Unwrap the very last wrapper list and pretty-print it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-p`, <s>14</s> 13 bytes

*-1 byte by porting [Neil's Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239880/16766)*

```
Lal:[lPEb]l@0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fJzGy0j66MjYnwNUqqfL///@6Bf9N/ycCAA)

#### Explanation

```
Lal:[lPEb]l@0
               l is empty list; a,b are command-line args
La             Loop a times:
        b       b
      PE        Prepended to
     l          Current list
    [    ]      Wrap that result in a singleton list
  l:            Assign back to l
          l    After the loop, l is our desired result wrapped in a singleton list
           @0  So get the first element
               and autoprint it, formatted as a list (-p flag)
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 27 bytes

```javascript
f=(c,n)=>--n?[c,f(c,n)]:[c]
```

[Try it out online](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjWSdP09ZOVzfPPjpZJw3MjbWKTo79n5yfV5yfk6qXk5@ukaahnqiuo2CsqfkfAA).

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 50 bytes

```lua
n,v=...t={v}for i=2,n do t={v,t}n=n-1 end return t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/T6fMVk9Pr8S2uqw2Lb9IIdPWSCdPISVfASSiU1KbZ5una6iQmpeiUJRaUlqUp1Dy/z8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 31 bytes

```
L$`¶
$`*$([$', )$`*]
, (]+)$
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/30cl4dA2LpUELRWNaBV1HQVNIDOWS0dBI1ZbU4VLBajCjEs9UR0A) Takes `n` and `value` on separate lines. Explanation:

```
L$`¶
```

Match the newline between `n` and `value`. This puts `n` in `` $` `` and `value` in `$'`.

```
$`*$([$', )$`*]
```

Wrap `value` in `n` lists.

```
, (]+)$
$1
```

Remove the trailing comma in the innermost list.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 56 bytes

```c
i;f(*x,n){for(i=~n;++i<n;)printf(i<0?",[%s"-i/n:"]",x);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HczBCoJAEIDh@z7FMhDs5Ep1ChqXHkQ9LNLWgI2yaghir76l1w/@v8mb1sszJaZgjrMVXEIXDbuvUJZxIYR9ZBmD4eJ8B1seBsj5JDeowc5Ia2pePuqPb6dHWTuowFcApN6exeCi9H6TUbO7EBfXbbqxDmZvLCP10zgYAKQ/K72qNf0A)

Takes a string literal as *value* and *n* , prints to std out the result.

````c
for(i=~n;++i<n;)      - iterate from -n to n

printf(i<0?  - select format string:
",[%s"-i/n..x)  * new nest, -i/n to skip comma at first stage
:"]"            * close nest
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org/), 38 bytes:

```
f=lambda n,v:[v,f(n-1,v)]if n>1else[v]
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIU@nzCq6TCdNI0/XUKdMMzYzTSHPzjA1pzg1uiz2f0FRZl6JRpqGqY6CeqK6puZ/AA)

Comment: This doesn't work for `n=1`

Comment: @pxeger Edited mine!

Comment: 36 bytes now...

Comment: You can't remove the `f=` because this is a recursive function which requires itself to be assigned to `f`

Comment: @pxeger dingledooper did

Comment: dingledooper's answer doesn't need to recursively call itself, so it can be a function expression

Comment: @pxeger I get it, new to golfing, very sorry!

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 53 bytes:

-7 bytes with `\` instead of `function`.

```
f=function(n,v)if(n>1){list(v,f(n-1,v))}else{list(v)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P802rTQvuSQzP08jT6dMMzNNI8/OULM6J7O4RKNMB8jTNQQKa9am5hSnQkU1a/@nFJSWaKRpmOooqCeqa2r@BwA)