# Create \$n\$ sublists with the powers of two (1, 2, 4, 8, 16...)

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, array

### Challenge:

Given the input number `n`. It should give me nested sublists of `n` layers with the [power of two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two) numbers for each level. Each power of two value will be in separate sublists.

### Notes:

- `n` will always be greater than 0
- I am using the example output with Python Lists. You can use any type of sequence in your own language.
- Your output must be one-indexed, add one to `n` if your output is zero-indexed.
- Your output sequence must be nested.

### Test cases:

```python
n = 1: [1]
n = 2: [1, [2]]
n = 3: [1, [2, [4]]]
n = 4: [1, [2, [4, [8]]]]
n = 5: [1, [2, [4, [8, [16]]]]]
n = 6: [1, [2, [4, [8, [16, [32]]]]]]
n = 7: [1, [2, [4, [8, [16, [32, [64]]]]]]]
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

<sub>The [power of twos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two) are these values `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048...`, each values is double of the previous value.</sub>

Comment: There are a number of issues with this challenge. It seems to be multiple challenges at once: Geometric sequence and the sublist formatting. See https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20905/91213

Comment: @tsh It has to be `[1, [2, [4, [8]]]]`

Comment: Consider posting in the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc) to get feedback on your challenges before posting them.

Comment: @tsh I want the values of `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048` and so on...

Comment: @mousetail I think that this is part of the challenge, it only has one input.

Comment: @mousetail What should I improve on for you to not downvote?

Comment: @tsh I edited my question to clarify what are geometric sequences.

Comment: I think in this case, you probably meant geometric sequence as the powers of two.

Comment: @u-ndefined I clarified it in my question :)

Comment: @tsh I changed it to "power of 2"

Comment: Can we output zero-indexed? (`3` => `[1, [2, [4, [8]]]]`)

Comment: @hyper-neutrino It has to be one-indexed, clarified it into my question.

Comment: @LuisMendo It must be nested. I will edit that in

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47351/16766)

Comment: Can input and output be unary?

Answer (score 7):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.polynomials`, 47 bytes

```factor
[ 2 powers reverse 1 cut [ swap 2array ] each ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcsxDsIwDAXQnVP8E1SiYoIDIBYWxFR1sCKjVriJsd1WOX1ATG96L0pRrD0ft/v1jIVi6rRIzWWZSRzOn5VzYsebLbOAzKg61Diiqs05cDmc2oAeWnY2h/H2g3FEWgMDfCdF/38YwZQmjC2RCLr2BQ)

```
        ! 4
2       ! 4 2
powers  ! { 1 2 4 8 }
reverse ! { 8 4 2 1 }
1       ! { 8 4 2 1 } 1
cut     ! { 8 } { 4 2 1 }
        ! { 8 } 4              <<first iteration of each>>
swap    ! 4 { 8 }
2array  ! { 4 { 8 } }
        ! { 4 { 8 } } 2        <<second iteration>>
swap    ! 2 { 4 { 8 } }
2array  ! { 2 { 4 { 8 } } }
        ! { 2 { 4 { 8 } } } 1  <<third>>
swap    ! 1 { 2 { 4 { 8 } } }
2array  ! { 1 { 2 { 4 { 8 } } } }
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>9</s> 6 bytes

```
(d1$"ꜝ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCI2IiwiKGQxJFwi6pydIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Uses the fact that [stack languages can have their input placed on the stack before execution](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22106/78850)

[Proof the meta proposal was +6 at the time of posting](https://web.archive.org/web/20221221235837/https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/22106)

### Explained

A port of Jelly

```
(d1$"ꜝ
(      # repeat input times
 d     # double
  1$"  # [1, that]
     ꜝ #  keep only truthy items
```

Comment: Exactly what I want! Upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 47 bytes

```
1i:?v~~l?^;
/$-1/
/on$o"[,":
\2*$:}10./"]"o~60.
```

[Try it!](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiMWk6P3Z+fmw/Xjtcbi8kLTEvXG4vb24kb1wiWyxcIjpcblxcMiokOn0xMC4vXCJdXCJvfjYwLiIsImlucHV0IjoiXHUwMDAzIiwic3RhY2siOiIiLCJtb2RlIjoibnVtYmVycyJ9)

[image]

Generates trailing commas at the end of lists, some languages allow that so that should be OK. Takes input as a char code.

Uses the length of the stack to keep track of how many `]` to generate at the end.

Comment: It works! Upvoted! This language is cool :) Did you create it?

Comment: Yea Fish is amazingly fun to program in

Comment: No, I created the online interpreter myself but the language was made by Harypon

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 44 bytes

```python
e=lambda n,i=1:[i,e(n-1, i*2)]if n>0 else[i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrBCsIwEEXRvV/xdp1IFKsbCcQfKV1EnOqDdlpiNiJ@e8yFuzvbp7xWu9SqcU7L/ZFgnrEPA72KHXoP7s9u5AS7naDzWweOdVozCBpysqdKU1cXdmhtmVakM0R8f6HdHRteUhF6qNA5V/8)

Comment: Nice answer, +1. You can save two bytes! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCsIwEEbhvaf4d52RKEY3EogXKV1EnOpAOy0xGyk9e8yDb/fWX/ksdqtV4pTm5yvBnEYfenVCdvJOj1cedIQ9LjJ9pdehjkuGQg052VvIO9w5HNBas1qhzhCx7aHpzm2eUyF1EFJmrn8 "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: 40 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxCsMwDEDRvafQFimooW6XYnAvEjIoxGkFiRyMlxJ6dtcf3vaPb/kke9Qawyb7vAgYa3DeXjexZVSOaFfH2t9pSnnUqa4pg4IaZLF3RMfwJH@B1pHVCnYGAc6fb7qhzbsUVIaISkT1Dw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Since `0` is logically false in Python and other numbers are logically true, you don't need the comparison operator: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcoxCgIxEEbh3lP83c7IKEQbCeQkyxYjG3XAnSwhjYhnj3nwdW//tFfxa@85vXW7rwoXSyE61NfZJJOfgtjxwkupsy39USoM5qjqz0xBcON4wGiv5o0mR8L3F4fpPOZNG5kgkzFz/wM)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
Ḥ1,¹ƇƲ¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//4bikMSzCucaHxrLCof/Dh8WS4bmY/zc)

-2 bytes thanks to caird coinheringaahing (use STDIN to avoid needing the leading `0`, and a shorter way of filtering the `0`)

```
Ḥ1,¹ƇƲ¡    Main Link (input in STDIN, so argument starts at 0)
      ¡    repeat N times
Ḥ          double the current list
 1,        pair with 1
   ¹Ƈ      filter by identity; remove falsy elements (filter out the 0 in the first step)
```

Comment: Nice answer! Equal to lyxal's 9 bytes.

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//4bikMSzCucaHxrLCof/Dh8WS4bmY/zc)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing can't believe I didn't think of that - thanks

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>36</s> 34 bytes

```ruby
->n{*r=k=2**n;n.times{r=k/=2,r};r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWqvINtvWSEsrzzpPryQzN7W4Giigb2ukU1RrXVT7v0AhLdo09j8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
F·Xs‚ZK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f7dD2iOJHDbOivP//NwUA)

Port of lyxal's Vyxal answer.

- -1 thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

#### Explanations:

```python
F·Xs‚ZK   # Implicit input (n)
F         # for i in range(a):
 ·        #  Double
  Xs‚     #  Get [1, that] (X defaults to 1)
     ZK   #  Push the list without the maximum
```

Previous 8 byte answer:

```python
L<o`¸¹G‚   # Implicit input (n)
L<         # range(0, n)
  o        # 2 to the power of each
   `¸      # Dump onto stack, putting the last one in a list
     ¹G    # n-1 times:
       ‚   #  Pair
```

Previous 13 byte answer:

```python
<Do¸sE¹<N-o‚R   # Implicit input (n)
<               # Reduce n by 1
 Do¸            # Duplicate and push [2**(n-1)] to the stack
    sE          # Swap and loop through range(0, n-1):
      ¹<N-      #  Subtract from n-1
          o     #  Raise 2 to the power of this number
           ‚R   #  Pair and reverse
```

Comment: Haha, wow! Impressive.

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f7dD2iOJHDbOivP//NwUA) (still a port of Lyxal's Vyxal answer).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks

Comment: The rare double port, porting and then being outgolfed by porting :p

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 44 bytes

```
f=\(n,k=1,`+`=list)`if`(n-1,k+f(n-1,k*2),+k)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGCpaUlaboWN3XSbGM08nSybQ11ErQTbHMyi0s0EzLTEjTydA11srXTILSWkaaOdrYmRM_mNA1DTa40DSMQYQwiTKAyMFMB)

Comment: A shame [this](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCjq/A/rTQvuSQzP08jT6fS1ihOw9AqT9dQUzMoNaU0OVUjJ7O4RKdSRydE83@ahrHmfwA) doesn't work.

Comment: @Giuseppe yep. I also hoped for `relist`, but simple recursion seems to be the shortest...

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 31 bytes

```javascript
f=(x,i=1)=>--x?[i,f(x,i*2)]:[i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVajQifT1lDT1k5Xt8I@OlMnDSSgZaQZaxWdGfu/oCgzr8Q2OT@vOD8nVS8nP50LLKKRpmGoqQlnGyGxjZHYJkhsUyS2GRLbXFPzPwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20 bytes

```
L+[^2b)?qtQbY[yhb)y0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/30c7Os4oSdO@sCQwKTK6MiNJs9Lg/39zAA)

```
L                      # Function y with input as b
 +                     # Append
  [^2b)                # List with 2^b as only element
       ?               # Ternary operator
        qtQb           # If b is equal to input - 1
            Y          #  empty list (when condition is true)
             [yhb)     # Call function y with input b+1 and put inside a list (when condition is false)
                  y0   # Call function y with input 0
```

Comment: [-4 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/30c7zkg3MMm@JCm2siQpsvL/f3MA)  Two bytes since you can use ]... instead of [...) for single element lists, another saved by counting down instead of up allowing the implicit Q at the end, and another saved by getting rid of the first ] (+ on a non list and a list will automatically append)

Comment: Yet more trickery can bring it down to [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/30c7I0mtJCm2siSpMs7H6P9/cwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 28 bytes

```
FiR,a{YlAEyPE EiUi=a?Y Hy0}y
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJGaVIsYXtZbEFFeVBFIEVpVWk9YT9ZIEh5MH15IiwiIiwiNyIsIi1wIl0=)

````
FiR,a{YlAEyPE EiUi=a?Y Hy0}y
FiR,a{                    }    Loop through [a, 0]
      YlAEyPE Ei               Set y (initially "") to y + 2**i wrapped in a list
                Ui=a?Y Hy0     Remove the empty string if it is the first iteration

```
````

Comment: You have a stray nil in the innermost list that probably shouldn't be there...

Comment: @DLosc shouldn't nil print nothing?

Comment: The str of nil is nothing, but the repr of nil is `()`. Since it's in a list and you're using the `-p` flag, you get the repr.

Comment: Hint: since the empty string is falsey and all the other values involved are truthy, you can remove the empty string using `FI`.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
:qWP"@XhP]&D
```

Try it at [**MATL online**](https://matl.io/?code=%3AqWP%22%40XhP%5D%26D&inputs=7&version=22.7.4)!

```
:       % Implicit input, n. Range [1 2 ... n]
q       % Subtract 1, element-wise
W       % Powers of 2, element-wise
P       % Flip. Gives [2^(n-1) 2^(n-2) ··· 1]
"       % For each number in that vector
@       % Push current number
  Xh    %   Concatenate all stack contents into a cell array
  P     %   Flip
]       % End
&D      % String representation. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2), 35 bytes

```
;=l,=c/^2=pP2;W=p-EpT=l+,=c/c 2,lDl
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7PWwsPWMvXjI9cFAyO1c9cC1FcFQ9bCssPWMvYyAyLGxEbCIsIjciLCIyLjAiXQ==)

Looks golfable.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 17 bytes

```
{(x-1)(1,,2*)/,1}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6rWqNA11NQw1NEx0tLU1zGs5eJKUzDlAgBOBQVb)

###### Explanation:

```
{(x-1)(1,,2*)/,1}
              ,1  start with list one
 (x-1)       /    do n-1 times
      (1,,2*)     1 joined with double the current value enlisted
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 68 bytes

```python
def f(n):
	for i in range(n):l=i and[l[0]//2,l]or[2**n//2]
	return l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tci9CoAgFEDhOZ/ijhqBZT9D0JOIQ5CWINe42NDTWw2B23fOeacjYp@nvFkHjqOYWeUigQePQCvu9nth8bDipoNujZSqCSaSVnWNbxhWkU0XIYR8ksfEHe@EYL9V4b7wUHgsPL3ODw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>48</s> <s>42</s> 40 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,c=1:n>1and[c,f(n-1,c+c)]or[c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIU8n2dbQKs/OMDEvJTpZJ00jT9dQJ1k7WTM2vyg6OfZ/QVFmXolGmoahpiYXjG2ExDZGYpsgsU2R2GZIbHNNzf8A)

*-6 bytes thanks to l4m2*

*-2 bytes thanks to The Thonnu*

Comment: Store 2**c rather than c saves some

Comment: @l4m2 Really? How?

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIU8n2dbQKjpZJ00jT9dQJ1k7WTM2M00hz84wNac4NTo59n9BUWZeiUaahqGmJheMbYTENkZimyCxTZHYZkhsc03N/wA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @l4m2 Thanks!!!

Comment: "x if y else z" can (sometime) by simplify into "y and x or z" (if x is always truthy for example)

Comment: 40 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIU8n2dbQKs/OMDEvJTpZJ00jT9dQJ1k7WTM2vyg6OfZ/QVFmXolGmoahpiYXjG2ExDZGYpsgsU2R2GZIbHNNzf8A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @TheThonnu What a great idea!

Comment: @tsh Thanks! Cool

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIU8n2dbQylBfP08rOjk2vyg6WSdNI0/XUCdZO1kz9n9BUWZeiUaahqGmJheMbYTENkZimyCxTZHYZkhsc03N/wA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
ＦＮ≔Φ⟦¹⊗υ⟧κυ⭆¹υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NTwbG4ODM9T8MtM6cEKBBtqKPgkl@alJOaolGqGaujkK2po1Cqac0VUJSZV6IRXAKk0n0TCzQMQcKa1v//m/7XLcsBAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＮ
```

Repeat `n` times...

```
≔Φ⟦¹⊗υ⟧κυ
```

... double the predefined empty list and prepend a `1` (but on the first pass filter out the list as it is empty).

```
⭆¹υ
```

Pretty-print the final list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 36 bytes

```
"$&"{`\d+
$.(*2*
.+
[1, $&]
, \d+]
]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9JRU2pOiEmRZtLRU9Dy0iLS0@bK9pQR0FFLZZLRwEoHssV@/@/IZcRlzGXCZcplxmXOQA) Link includes test cases (because fortunately I was able to use `$&` instead of `$+`). Explanation:

```
"$&"{`
```

Repeat the program `n` times (because `n` is the input).

```
\d+
$.(*2*
```

Double all of the integers.

```
.+
[1, $&]
```

Wrap the list with `1` in a sublist.

```
, \d+]
]
```

Remove the original input.

Answer (score 2):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 19 bytes

```
[1]"2*1rev ,";1- *#
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-sclin) Takes the argument from the next line. If outputting as an infinite sequence were allowed, then something like `1,,"2*1rev ,"itr` would be 16 bytes.

For testing purposes:

```
; n>o
1,,"2*1rev ,";1- *#
7
```

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
[1] ( 2* 1rev , ) ;1- *#
```

- `[1]` starting with 1-length array of 1
- `(...) ;1- *#` repeat (next line) - 1 times...

  - `2* 1rev ,` vectorized-multiply by 2 and prepend 1

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 23 bytes

```
[1],{[1,2 «*«$_]}...*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1up4FCsYPs/2jBWpzraUMdI4dBqrUOrVeJja/X09LT@WyvoFSdWKqTlFwHVRccZGsT@BwA)

This is an expression for the infinite sequence of arrays.  The magic is in the `«*«` operator, which multiplies each element of an arbitrarily-deeply nested structure by a number.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-p`, <s>18</s> 14 bytes

```
FI[EiUi<a&REa]
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJGSVtFaVVpPGEmUkVhXSIsIiIsIjciLCItcCJd)

-4 bytes thanks to @DLosc

Recursively builds the nested lists. `FI` is used to filter out the `0` in the last list, otherwise `[1;[2;[4;0]]]` would be output.

Comment: Nice solution! Here's [14 bytes](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJGSVtFaVVpPGEmUkVhXSIsIiIsIjciLCItcCJd).

Comment: @DLosc that's really interesting that you don't need a seperator in the list, might come in handy in the future

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-p`, 12 bytes

```
LaYFI[1y*2]y
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJMYVlGSVsxeSoyXXkiLCIiLCI3IiwiLXAiXQ==)

#### Explanation

Same idea as [hyper-neutrino's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255809/16766):

```
LaYFI[1y*2]y
              a is command-line argument; y is "" (implicit)
La            Loop a times:
       y*2      Multiply y by 2 (-> 0 if it's "", element-wise if it's a list)
     [1   ]     Put 1 and that value in a list
   FI           Filter, removing falsey values (in this case, 0)
  Y             Yank, assigning the result back to y
           y  After the loop, autoprint the final value of y
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
Æ∞1\αç
```

Port of [*@lyxal*'s Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255805/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9w26OOeYYx5zYeXv7/vyGXEZcxlwmXKZcZlzmXoQEA)

**Explanation:**

```python
Æ       # Loop the (implicit) input amount of times,
        # using the following five characters as inner code-block:
 ∞      #  Double all current values (the stack contains a 0 by default)
  1\α   #  Pair it with a leading 1
     ç  #  Falsey filter to remove the 0
        # (after the loop, the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 21 bytes

```
!n=[n<2||[1,2*!~-n];]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcxBCsIwEAXQfU7xM7hIpILpUpuC5yhdFI0wEsYQIqRQvHq66TvA@/wiL662psVPMvTbNrmuP@v/Reb73FTKoZTVVAuPHFJcnsHQybhqqQM9ZCU/Elml3t8MBgvczV0VgJRZShTD8COORrO1Ksir7Q)

using `√` instead of `!` would save a character, since `a√b` is parsed as `a*√b` (which doesn't work for `!`). But of course the byte count would be higher.

Answer (score 1):

## [FunStack](https://github.com/dloscutoff/funstack) alpha, 40 bytes

```
Pair 1 Double over iterate Wrap 1 At Dec
```

Try it at [Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/funstack): pass the input number as a command-line argument and enter the program on stdin.

#### Explanation

First, we generate the infinite sequence of such nested lists:

```
Pair 1
```

Given `x`, turn it into `[1, x]`.

```
Double
```

Multiply by 2 (applies itemwise over lists).

```
over
```

Given two arity-1 functions, this modifier works the same as `compose` but is 3 bytes shorter. The composed function is "Multiply the argument by 2 and pair 1 with the result."

```
iterate
```

Repeatedly apply this function and return the infinite list of results...

```
Wrap 1
```

... starting at `[1]`.

The resulting infinite list is a value at the left side of the program, so it gets pushed onto the argument list. Then:

```
At
```

Get the nth element, where n is...

```
Dec
```

... the first program argument, decremented (since indexing is 0-based).

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 14 bytes

```
{,W%{2\#]W%}%}
```

Anonymous code block that pops a number from the stack and pushes the nested array.

The header reads the input. The footer executes the block and prints the string representation of the array.

Port of my [MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255820/36398).

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1flPm/WidctdooRjk2XLVWtfZ/XcF/UwA)

#### Code explanation

```
{,W%{2\#]W%}%}

{            }   e# define code block
 ,               e#   range (0-based)
  W%             e#   reverse array
    {      }%    e#   map this code block over the array
     2\#         e#     exponential with case 2 
        ]        e#     pack all stack contents into an array
         W%      e#     reverse array
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>11</s> 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
o!²ÔòÎr!p
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=byGy1PLOciFw&input=Ny1R)

Explanation:

```
o!²ÔòÎr!p
o         # For X in [0...n-1]:
 !²       #  2 to the power of X
   Ô      # Reverse that array
    òÎ    # Partition between every non-zero element
      r   # Reduce:
       !p #  Push the previous result at the end of the next item
```

Comment: [11 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=xlsycFhdw9RyIXA&input=Ny1R)

Comment: [9 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=byGy1PLOciFw&input=Ny1R)

Answer (score 1):

## [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) 39 bytes

With `n=5`

```
s=Nothing;Do[s={2^--i,s},{i,n,1,-1}];s
```

> {1, {2, {4, {8, {16}}}}}

Answer (score 1):

`awk` solution - different solutions for `mawk-1/2` and `gawk/nawk` :

```
jot 16 |
```

> ```
> mawk 'function __(_){return $_=--_?_+=_=__(_):!_}__(NF=$_)' OFS=,
> ```

> ```
> nawk
> gawk 'func __(_){return $++_=--_?__(_)/_*(_+_):!_}__(NF=$-_)' OFS=,
>
>  * "function" is normally preferred, but this is Pebble Beach…
> ```

```
1
1,2
1,2,4
1,2,4,8
1,2,4,8,16
1,2,4,8,16,32
1,2,4,8,16,32,64
1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128
1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256
1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512
1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024
1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048
1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096
1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192
1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384
1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768
1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768,65536
```

Different solutions needed stemming from their different order of precedence of something not clearly specified in `POSIX` -

- `mawk`s go ***strictly*** left-to-right, even for assignments,

  — so `$_ = ...` is equivalent to `$(func-input-val) = ...`,
- while `gawk/nawk` handles all of RHS first, with LHS taking on final value of `_`

To make nesting sublists out of that :

```
 for __ in $(jot 7); do 
  
    echo " $__ :: $( echo "$__"  | 
      
       mawk 'function __(_){ORS="]"ORS;return $_=\
             --_?_+=_=__(_):!_}$!__(NF=$(OFS=",["))="["$_' 

    )"
 done

 1 :: [1]
 2 :: [1,[2]]
 3 :: [1,[2,[4]]]
 4 :: [1,[2,[4,[8]]]]
 5 :: [1,[2,[4,[8,[16]]]]]
 6 :: [1,[2,[4,[8,[16,[32]]]]]]
 7 :: [1,[2,[4,[8,[16,[32,[64]]]]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 70 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY4xC4MwEIV3f8UhDrmiULsUQi04FtqpdBKH1Ea5Ys@SZJHgb0@NPbgH9/ge72ynRhWm51t3Dm6KGHwC8NI9fNZDKDNYCbUxam7uzhAPLUp4MDmowIfIacHywi6nqFWJ8krWNTXPbeWpF3zeY3QE5StZlDntDoh6tBr@Ni6hnwwIglMBJbgJjrg9Eee7VrqRhU15LcxIQuZ1zKS4EUsSd0nCDw)

```scala
def e(n:Int,i:Int=1):List[Any]={if(n>0)List(i,e(n-1,i*2))else List(i)}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 59 bytes

```lua
load"a={1}b=a for i=2,...do b[2]={2^i/2}b=b[2]end return a"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/disMgEIXv@xSH3BihWOr@XfkkSxdMY7ISq8FoYQndV89qI3RLBJH5jufMjIly6cVinGwrKebjrRESnfPQgu8ZY61D88lPYuZf@sCTmitlW3gVoreQ1dJFew7aWbTxMtaO7gDoDuFnVKmCECBBNkYRhG9ls5qOcWdpMCGJmEEKzY2H/RXaYpTaT9nfuiL@ix0ofpPTxkuj/JqLIWdVhLGBsfQiDfkw5kYTGFtnvNKiPP6Ude5/CG7rRMpM6lkPbgpe276smf357sYEQ30P7@sjpfSZ8A152ZDXDXnbkPcN@Uhk@QM)

Ungolfed version:

```lua
function f(n)
    a={1}b=a
    for i=2,n do
        b[2]={2^i/2}
        b=b[2]
    end
    return a
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 74 bytes

```hs
data L=L Int [L] deriving Show
c(a:b)=L a[c b|b/=[]]
f n=c$(2^)<$>[0..n-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PyWxJFHBx9ZHwTOvRCHaJ1YhJbUosywzL10hOCO/nCtZI9EqSRMonRidrJBUk6RvGx0by5WmkGebrKJhFKdpo2IXbaCnl6drGPs/NzEzz7agKDOvRCVNxeQ/AA)

Comment: You can delete the spaces before and after `[L]`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 22 bytes

```
Nest[{1,2#}&,{1},#-1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773y@1uCS62lDHSLlWTafasFZHWdcwVu1/QFFmXomCvkO6vkNQYl56arShjnns//8A)

-9 bytes from @att

Comment: `Nest[{1,2#}&,{1},#-1]&`

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `r`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
{Ḍ1,æ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPTQmY29kZT0lN0IlRTElQjglOEMxJTJDJUMzJUE2JmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9JmZsYWdzPXI=)

Port of lyxal's Vyxal answer. Takes input [on the stack](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22106/114446). This default was [+11/-5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu1bk.png) at the time of posting ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20230605031557/https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods?page=3&tab=scoredesc)).

##### Explanation

```python
{Ḍ1,æ  # Implicit input
{      # Repeat input no. times:
 Ḍ     #  Double (vectorises)
  1,   #  Pair with 1
    æ  #  Only keep non-zero
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 64 bytes

```haskell
data L=L Int[L]deriving Show
m!1=L m[]
m!n=L m[(m*2)!(n-1)]
(1!)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWN51SEksSFXxsfRQ880qifWJTUosyyzLz0hWCM_LLuXIVDYEyudGxQFYemKWRq2WkqaiRp2uoGcuVZqthqKgJMWlTbmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgkaagglUAmYVAA)

Based on [Roman Czyborra's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/261079/98955). I'm using the same output format, which doesn't feel correct because there's an extra empty list…