# Keep elements in sequence that have a letter repeated at least 3 times

Tags: code-golf, string, sequence, array, data-structures

### Challenge:

Given the input array `l` with a list of strings, only keep the elements in the sequence that have a letter that's repeated at least 3 times. Like `'lessons'` has 3 `s` letters, so it should be kept in the sequence. But, `'lesson'` has only two `s` letters, so it should be removed.

### Notes:

- `l` will always be a sequence, and its elements will always be strings with only alphabetical characters.
- I am using the example output with Python Lists. You can use any type of sequence in your own language.

### Test cases:

```python
['element', 'photoshop', 'good'] -> ['element', 'photoshop']
['happy', 'colorful', 'luggage'] -> ['luggage']
['reference', 'tomorrow', 'today'] -> ['reference', 'tomorrow']
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: This is fine for now, but in future, please note that it's recommended to use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc) before you post your challenge, so you can get feedback on it first.

Comment: I will @TheThonnu next time.

Comment: @U12-Forward order doesn't matter right?

Comment: Can the input array have repeates?

Comment: @UndoneStudios It doesn't matter.

Comment: @xnor It might have repeates.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```python
lambda l:{s for s in l for c in s if s.count(c)>2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcdLCoAgEADQq8xOhWhRu6AuUi3MTwbmSNoiorNP2e69eGWHoSXbT@TlvmgJvrsTWDwgwRbA/1SF3y2kWuEZMldiaB6Kx/bZ8pEZb3YTMquARYcZk8NYsiJqNgtBLw)

Comment: Nice, I love the set unpack part.

Comment: @U12-Forward thanks, I learnt it from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50719/114446)

Comment: This will output a string multiple times if more than one of its letters appears three times.

Comment: @xnor fixed (by just changing the list comprehension to a set comprehension)

Comment: This is probably the most _pythonic_ code golf answer I've seen in a while

Comment: Note that this is now just a dupe of my answer.

Comment: @UndoneStudios I didn't intentionally copy your answer. But anyway, we have a consensus that duplicate answers are allowed: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/114446

Comment: Why not use semantic variable names, like `s` and `c` (instead of `i` and `j`) ?

Comment: @NiccoloM. I assume they were golfed down from `string` and `character`

Answer (score 6):

## [QuadS](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 13 bytes

Takes linebreak-separated text

```apl
(.).*\1.*\1
%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcYxDoAgEATAfv9hohYm/seGyAnFweIJMb4etZhkzub81fu4TMu8rT8MvYtKklxRIiuvyIJAeiC6Uh7sVNrRFNpCcEEAk0NM8i6oTDTj/cW75wU)

Search for…

`(.)` any character (1)
`.*` zero or more characters
`\1` character (1)
`.*` zero or more characters

and for each match, return:

`%` the entire line the match occurred on

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-f`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>7</s> 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ü d¤
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWY&code=/CBkpA&input=WyJyZWZlcmVuY2UiICJ0b21vcnJvdyIgInRvZGF5Il0KLVI)

```
ü d¤     :Implicit filter of input array
ü        :Group & sort
  d      :Any truthy (a non-empty string)
   ¤     :  Slice off the first 2 characters
```

### Without flag, 6 bytes

```
fÈü d¤
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Zsj8IGSk&input=WyJyZWZlcmVuY2UiICJ0b21vcnJvdyIgInRvZGF5Il0KLVI)

Answer (score 6):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <s>6.5</s> 5.5 bytes (11 nibbles)

*Edit: -2 bytes by using transpose, inspired by [Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255976/95126)*

```
|$>2`'=~$$
```

```
|$              # filter each word int the input by
      =~$       #   group the letters by
         $      #     themselves,
    `'          #   transpose this list of lists,
  >2            #   and remove the first 2 elements
                #   (so if there is at least one letter
                #   present >2 times, the resulting 
                #   list will have nonzero length)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 55 bytes

```python
lambda a:filter(lambda x:any(x.count(i)>2for i in x),a)
```

Returns a filter object. The asterisk is used in the output to unpack the filter object automatically.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#%23LclBCgIxDEDRq2TXRgYXuhvQi6iL1GltoJOUGqFz@uqAq8/j182yynmky30UWsNCQHPiYrH5v/tMsvl@fOpHzDNeT0kbMLBAx4lw1Ma/cUj@5mKJaxRzE7ia1fSdte54qS57iSiE4B6I4ws)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

```python
lambda a:filter(lambda x:any(x.count(i)>2for i in x),a)
```

Exactly the same code, just returns a normal Python list instead of a filter object, meaning you don't need to use the asterisk in the output (if that matters).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcnBCsIwDIDhV8mtDQwPOw70RdRDurU20CWlRuievjrw9PPx18OyyjzS9TEK7WEjoCVxsdj8330hOXy/rPoR84y3OWkDBhboOBGO2vg3kr@7WOIexdwErmY1fWetJ16q21kiCiG4J@L4Ag)

Comment: Nice first answer!

Answer (score 5):

## GNU grep -P, 11 bytes

```
(.).*\1.*\1
```

P.a. to selecting the language flavour for perl, I'm not counting -P (which sets the language flavour to PCRE from the default BRE).

"List of string" defined as "text file" (POSIX).

Test case typescript:

```
$ printf '%s\n' \
  'element' 'photoshop' 'good' \
  'happy' 'colorful' 'luggage' \
  'reference' 'tomorrow' 'today' \
| grep -P '(.).*\1.*\1'
element
photoshop
luggage
reference
tomorrow
```

Comment: Feel free to upvote my question :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 48 bytes

```python
lambda s:[c for c in s if max(map(c.count,c))>2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYxBDsIgFET3PcVPXABJ40J3JnqRygLpB5oAn1Ca2tNjiEl1obuZzHuTtuIonqu53qtX4TEqmC@DBkMZNEwRZpgMBPXkQSWuj5qWWHotxO0ka8pTLNzwgaHHgLGwHlhyVGh2lFqxRCOTQsAB/kCy@7w4ldLWZk2esll8y36xVlncX/b@JWY0mDFqbEKhQDnT@s6j2nb1Nyahqy8)

Comment: Nice! Unfortunately, I won't upvote it, because of the misleading variable names (`s` instead of `L`, `c` instead of `s`).

Comment: @NiccoloM. s&c for set of candidates. :)

Comment: That's a good excuse. Upvoted!

Comment: @NiccoloM. this is codegolf, generally no one cares what the variable names are because they are all arbitrary letters anyway

Comment: @jezza_99 And, tbh, I don't even type capital letters to begin with. u can see me not use them in the beginning of sentences. i don't capitalize the word "I", because that's just unnecessary english jargon. i don't type them at the beginning of names. i just type them if i absolutely have to.

Comment: @Joao-3 It's codegolf, not codeobfuscation. And naming a variable "l" is bad because it's hard to distinguish it from "1".

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 25 bytes

```ruby
->l{l.grep /(.).*\1.*\1/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYzBCsIwEETvfsWCh6jYFD/A/kjNIbab5JB2wzZBgvjtkVCRHvQwMLP7ZjjdczHX0nT@6aVlDNAe5FGebpeq9lUCmL4X6HHCOYoziOAo0uIo1GCJRqEU7KHp4A@mduuG0yHk@hrIE5vkq/fJWm1xs/G9fGqMBhnnASseaSJmeqx@1HlT/A0qKG8)

Comment: You can [knock out a couple bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFglXiEzrU5fQ09TTyvGEIT1//9PzUnNTc0r4SrIyC/JL87IL@BKz89P@ZdfUJKZn1f8XzcPAA) by making it a full program.

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v05fQ09TTyvGEIT11dQKijLzSv7/T81JzU3NK@EqyMgvyS/OyC/gSs/PT/mXX1CSmZ9X/F83DwA) using Jordan's idea.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-p`, 11 bytes

```
gFI2<M:^_N_
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJnRkkyPE06Xl9OXyIsIiIsImVsZW1lbnQgbGlzdCBnb29kIGNpdmlsaXphdGlvbiIsIi1wIl0=)

#### Explanation

```
gFI2<M:^_N_
g            List of command-line arguments
 FI          Filter by this function:
   2<          2 is less than
     M         the maximum of
      :        (force the precedence of unary M to be lower than its rhs)
         N_    the number of occurrences in the argument string of
       ^_      each character in the argument string
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
'sĠ'ḢḢ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCInc8SgJ+G4ouG4oiIsIiIsIlsncmVmZXJlbmNlJywgJ3RvbW9ycm93JywgJ3RvZGF5J10iXQ==)

### Explained

```
'sĠ'ḢḢ
'      # Filter input where:
 sĠ    #   sorted and grouped by consecutive
   'ḢḢ #   has items where length >= 3
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 37 bytes

I/O as an array of strings, using [<s>GB's</s> Adám's RegEx](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255906/58974).

```javascript
a=>a.filter(s=>/(.).*\1.*\1/.test(s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYtBDsIgEEX3nsIdYJTGA7QXURcTGGjNlCEw1fT0GOLOuPjJ@8l7T3hBdWXJcknssYWxwTiBDQsJFl3HadDW2NP92jdYwSq6GtMcp8qEljjqoG8KCVdMos5HlWcWrjPnfiKzVw9jDr/BDDnv3XBMXMJGnWmLESL@DQoGLJgcdlF45VL4/WUPe0/aBw)

### <s>44</s> 42 bytes

I/O as an array of character arrays.

```javascript
a=>a.filter(a=>a.some(c=>(a[c]=-~a[c])>2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1BDoMgEEX3PUV3QNKy6LbBixgTJzigBhgC2MZNr25Fd01X81/@f5kZXpB1mmK5BxpwMwpUYzlID5Fn1bRSytwJcfBegZxpCn0vnlZtB5vJFUxnl8kj16rh0OpO3T/1iOYhxKYpZHIoHVlueMvQocdQ2O3K4kiF8kixgiUa2P7v8iuMEONaF5ocJbO4mt1iLVj8KyQ0mDBorMNCnlKi95kHWKuyfQE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-p`, 14 bytes

```
{FIaM_Na>2}FIg
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJ7RklhTV9OYT4yfUZJZyIsIiIsImVsZW1lbnQgcGhvdG9zaG9wIGdvb2QiLCItcCJd)

```
{FIaM_Na>2}FIg
{         }FIg   Keep words that return truthy resuts for ...
   aM_Na>2       Does the letter appear more than two times?
 FI              Filter out falsy results (return either "1" or "")
```

Comment: FIg[​](https://example.com)

Comment: @Seggan Fig yay

Answer (score 3):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) `-En`, 14 bytes

```
/(.).*\1.*\1/p
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlebSSrmueUuyCpaUlaboW6_Q19DT1tGIMQVi_ACIIlVuwLTUnNTc1r4SrICO_JL84I7-AKz0_PwUiCwA)

Answer (score 3):

## x86 .COM, 48 bytes

```
0100  BA 2F 01 B8 03 0A 89 C7-89 C1 F3 AA CD 21 BE 31
0110  01 8A 4C FF 0F B6 D9 C7-40 01 0A 24 AC 89 C3 FE
0120  0F 74 04 E2 F7 EB D9 B2-31 B4 09 CD 21 EB D1 FF

org 100h
sta:    mov dx, bu
    mov ax, 0x0A03
    mov di, ax
    mov cx, ax
la: rep stosb
    int 21h
    mov si, bu+2
    mov cl, [si-1]
    movzx bx, cl
    mov [bx+si+1], word '$'*256+10
lb: lodsb
    mov bx,ax
    dec byte [bx]
    jz ok
    loop lb
    jmp sta
ok: mov dl, bu+2-$100
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    jmp sta
bu: db -1
```

Unluckily it behaves bad, input is also displayed

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ĠZṫɗƇ3
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of lists of characters and yields the filtered list.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///IgqiHO1efnH6s3fj/4Xbv//@j1VNzUnNT80rUdRTUCzLyS/KLM/ILQJz0/PwUEJ2RWFBQCWIk5@fkF6WV5oDYOaXp6YnpqSBmUWpaalFqXjKYU5Kfm19UlF8OYackVqrHAgA)**

#### How?

```
ĠZṫɗƇ3 - Link: words
     3 - set the right argument to three
    Ƈ  - filter (words) keeping those for which:
   ɗ   -   last three links as a dyad - f(word, 3):
Ġ      -     group indices by value - e.g. "aardvark" -> [[1,2,6],[4],[8],[3,7],[5]]
 Z     -     transpose                                   [[1,4,8,3,5],[2,7],[6]]
  ṫ    -     tail from index (3)                         [[6]]
       -     (an empty list is falsey)                   true (the third "a" gives the 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>54<sup>1</sup> 53</s> 50 bytes

To get the ball rollin'...

*-1 thanks to a fix pointed out by xnor
-3 bytes because sets are also fine*

```python
lambda n:{i for i in n for y in i if i.count(y)>2}
```

<sub>1: crossed out 54 still looks like 54 :(</sub>

Comment: Nice answer +1.

Comment: Note that your challenges are getting easier and easier. I suggest next time you try increasing the difficulty of your challenges.

Comment: Sure, I will take that to note.

Comment: [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255804/create-n-sublists-with-the-powers-of-two-1-2-4-8-16) wasn't hard though, so it was kinda fun trying to get a solution before I realised there was already an answer up there.

Comment: This will output a string multiple times if more than one of its letters appears three times.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 13 bytes

```
G`(.).*\1.*\1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZBCoAgEAXQ/ZykWgSdoku0SPKngfplUsLTWy0ePEW5kul93Yd5nKdt@fWOgIhUJHsW3p5ZHGnFm5ybHAysetYgoTpnHERxQpEOSGGkKp8v1rQX) Takes newline-separated words. Explanation: `G` is Retina's "grep" operation, which just keeps matching lines, according to the obvious regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
ＷＳ¿⊙ι›№ικ²⟦ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxDgIhDIDhvU/BCMm5uDoZB@Nm4mgcCNcDYo@SWrzw9Hhuf/58IXkJ7GmMLWVCY2@lNn2o5BKtcyYvxp5Lt3kyV0GvKPbCreh/vN1kjm5H912rfeaXO42BhCsWhZpY@ZO4QmSeIflaOwQmbrI0Amox@ogguKBgCQjKK4vwtsfsO4zDl34) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes newline-terminated words. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ
```

Loop through the words.

```
¿⊙ι›№ικ²
```

If any character appears more than twice, then...

```
⟦ι
```

... output the word on its own line.

9 bytes by taking the input in JSON format:

```
Φθ⊙ι›№ιλ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYmxDgIhEER/hVBxCTa2VsZEW/vLFYTbA5I9Flc4w9cj6DTz3oz1hi0ZbO3JIWZ1D5iB1UuLa6wqaPFgMGO5Uel3H3DS4jz1XFqbZwkIO8QstZDJU6a3pzTEEa2jvUmpDrCEVHgrOASLc8bBQIYNGKL9SaadmOnz59VUuSztdOAX) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 θ          Input array
Φ           Filtered where
   ι        Current word
  ⊙         Any character satisfies
     №      Count of
       λ    Current character
      ι     In current word
    ›       Is greater than
        ²   Literal integer `2`
            Implicitly output each match on its own line
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ĠẈ>2ẸµƇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Igoe7OuyMHu7acWjrsfb/h9u9NSP//49WT81JzU3NK1HXUVAvyMgvyS/OyC8AcdLz81PUY3UUotUzEgsKKkFCyfk5@UVppTkgdk5penpieipERVFqWmpRal5yKkimJD83v6govxzCTkmsVI8FAA)

### How it works

```
ĠẈ>2ẸµƇ - Main link. Takes a list of words L on the left
     µƇ - Filter L by the following:
Ġ       -   Group the indices of identical letters
 Ẉ      -   Length of each group
  >2    -   Greater than 2?
    Ẹ   -   Any true?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>95</s> <s>90</s> 85 bytes

- -5 thanks to l4m2
- -5 thanks to ceilingcat and c--

Lowercase strings only.

Iterates through each string and prints it as soon as it encounters 3 of a letter, skipping the string otherwise. Rather than clear the counters each time, I simply create brand new counters.

```c
f(int**s){for(char*t,*i;t=*s;*t&&puts(*s),s++)for(i=calloc(99,9);*t&&++i[*t]<3;t++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVAxboQwEOz9ihWRTtj40qRCPu4Fp3SpEAUxBiwZFtlLohPi7cS@6xIp23jGO6NZjT4PWh9Hn9uZhAh869Hnemy9ICmsokoEJeh0WlYKedzLUBQ8aWylW@dQ52UpS/7QFIWtBTWXN0VRpPbjxc7arZ2BS6DO2c/X8cpYDGJTa@f8C23H2cYAUh7E9LqpEgV4XlA3HDbIjDOTmSmTkC0jEoYRl0QGxC6@7x@3G@zyr29sl@WehBod@n51Cbt1GNrB/OfzpjfezDqJMsIJvcfvJ@7a@y9nwhHsMt4vSDEWSaqHqqAgfsCjuOycJuMSUjPQ54K4YvvxAw)

Comment: [92](https://tio.run/##fVAxbsMwDNz9CkIFAklWunQKFPcFQbdOhgdXlm0VsmlIdIsg8NtdKe3UAuXCO/IOJM4cB2P2XTr1rnseFQkztkHKqCTpW4@Baxm1pMNhWSlyGYWKZSnywlWm9R4NP53USSiqfoRl6WpJzflJU1LqbX9ws/FrZ@EcqfPu7XF8Lgo3E0ytm/kHuk7ArQDIlyGdrpsqUwB@/6Vu0hqY9XayMzEFbBmRMI64ZDIgdqm/vF4usKm/vrFdlmsWGvQY@tVn7NdhaAf7ny/Y3gY7myxihBOGgJ/fuGuvv5wZJ7Cp9H8KrigSyRlRFTWkAdzTY8dcTCjIyUDPJQldbPsX)

Comment: Also your `j` isn't used

Comment: [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##fZBBa4QwEIXv@RVDCotGt9D2UsjaX7D01pPswcaogehIMrYs4m@3k91bC80l7yXfy4Rnjr0x@95lbiKlYr52GDIzNEGRpkpFrehwmBeKGV@WsSjyBDAMrn56fr1U63ZDisLVii6nF03M6G1/cJPxS2vhFKn17vNxeBOCc2Js3JR9oWtzsQqANAt4cs1PsQW4T68vOawgrbejnUiWIOcBCeOAczI9Ysv7@8f5DFv5Nzc083xNoEGPoVt80n7p@6a3/@WC7Wywk0mQJBwxBPy@67a5/komzWIr@f9clxBsUjtURQ18ALfe5DEtmZeQmoEuU5Rrse0/) and it doesn't leak, not that it matters

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 100 bytes

```java
l->{l.removeIf(s->s.chars().noneMatch(c->s.length()-s.replace(""+(char)c,"").length()>2));return l;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVAxbsMwDJybVxCaJDTW0DWtgY4Fkilj0UGVZVsuLRkinSII8nZXro0gKNDbyDvyeOzMyRRd9TUN4yd6CxYNERyMD3DZbCDDB3apNtbBPrdgRZfn9Mge9d4TPx85@dCUUMt/CFS739nrspTYcHbbA8LLhEV5QZ1cH0/urZZUlKRtaxJJpUMM7mDYttLObXSh4VaqgrJ@wHyVFOJRzmplt0Kom6J8UmqXHI8pAO6u02K/plztT9FX0Oescjnz/QNMakjlnA/HM7HrdRxZD5ljDBJ1LYP7vsv@mpI53@eUfzjShmZeCoeud4HFFsTQRo7UxmEumhgroTJu/7lOPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 11 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function taking a list of strings

```apl
⊢/⍨3∊¨3⌊⍧⍨¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYmxDcIwEEV7pkjnKqLICDTQEhaw4rNTODnLOILUSBGycAQFC9CQAomGCTLKLWKsNF/vv8eNzkXPNaoczg5aASJG8q81hamgq5/T3jyFd/rzFCUNdwoj@QuFD4Xf/C1oeND4LPebtIftrowyY6ChgdaxjJkaHR5rNIkVomCrlGtuTJ9EhRqt7HRC3SnFFSzZggQLbQXJO2zQWjwtKHjP/g)

`⊢` the argument…

`/⍨` filtered by…

`3∊¨` whether 3 is a member of each,…

`3⌊` where 3 caps the values of…

`⍧⍨¨` the self-counts for each

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
.-#+GGQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X09XWdvdPfD//2j11JzU3NS8EnUdBfWCjPyS/OKM/AIQJz0/P0U9FgA)

#### Explanation

```
  #        # filter each element of
      Q    # eval(input())
.-         # on the bag-wise subtraction of
   +GG     # two alphabets concatenated
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `math.unicode`, 43 bytes

```factor
[ [ histogram values [ 2 > ] ∃ ] filter ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY4xTsQwEEX7PcXv0aagQotEi2hoEFW0heWMHUt2xrHHRNFqq224A02a5QKcZltOgiEIMcWfr9Gbr__2bpQWTsvl4_np4fF-B5Uz64ygpP-RJosSl8X9HpsyOM0dISYSmWNyg2CckGksNGjKuN0cNqgzTgeQp0AViD0L554jLHOH4x_QqxhnaPacTPHwxVpl6R-QyFD6DoZw4JR4qqZTc0WO5yJme3O5atGirx3ZJhXwonypNVpc4w57fL6eqhrnhRL268s5qIhm9cuy7i8)

- `[ ... ] filter` Select sequences whose
- `histogram` histograms
- `values [ ... ] ∃` contain any values
- `2 >` greater than two

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 54 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
r=filter(any((>2).length).group.sort)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcoxDoMwDADAva@wIoZEQhnYYerYH1QMHlKwME5kuwOvD1263XA72lGYe6ezVXV4omN@kflD5w@xF40oV4zLlDIX2XxPedP6bdl@PfUTSWCGpiQOAyi8IXAxq2Jh/DPA2m8)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ʒD¢à3@
```

I/O as a list of lists of characters.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//1CSXQ4sOLzB2@P8/OlopR0lHKRWIi6E4H4jzwOxYHVyyIBmQKEw2F0qD9JWAZQuArAyo@hIoXYwkVgBWlQ7lgXAKWAQknwiWh@BKsGgyVE0OlC4C4jQgLgWLwdwJ4qVDcSKUTgXLFkHdlwali5DcmwxXBXNnLpItRVB2OYqKFKgNQNfFAgA)

**Old 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answers with I/O as a list of strings:**

```
ʒ{Åγà3@
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LcuxDcIwFEXRXVzTsQB7RBQmebGRHD/rf0coomYBJmAHRkhHwUrmB6W6p7lUf7mitc/zvj6@7/V1PLXWuQRVZnWHXQYkTMjVVCIrNbKYAzlYoi9lsfZMlHFO2ziH4ANMghGC3G@unCjC25@DX9z5Bw)

`{Åγà` could alternatively be `D.M¢` for the same byte-count:
[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LcuxDcIwFEXRXVxHaViAIm0mQBQmebGRHD/rf0coazACo1CylPlBVPc0l@pvd7T2eQ79@H6dzq1dXIIqs7ruLwMSVuRqKpGVGlnMgZwt0ZeyWycmyrKlY9xC8AEmwQJBng5XrhTh48fZ7@76BQ)

**Explanation:**

```python
ʒ       # Filter the (implicit) input-list of lists of characters:
 D      #  Duplicate the current list of characters
  ¢     #  Pop both, and count how many times each character occurs in the list
   à    #  Pop and leave the maximum
    3@  #  Check whether this maximum is >= 3
        # (after which the filtered list of lists of characters is output implicitly)

ʒ       # Filter the (implicit) input-list of strings:
 {      #  Sort the characters in the string
  Åγ    #  Run-length encode it; pushing a list of characters and lengths separated to
        #  the stack
    à   #  Pop the list of lengths and leave its maximum
     3@ #  Check whether this maximum is >= 3
        # (after which the filtered list of strings is output implicitly)

 D      #  Duplicate the current string
  .M    #  Pop and push its most frequently occurring character
    ¢   #  Pop both, and count how many times this most frequent character occurs in the
        #  string
```

Answer (score 1):

## QB45, 122 bytes

```
for t=1to n:redim p(26):for i=1to len(a$(t)):v=asc(mid$(a$(t),i,1))-96:p(v)=p(v)+1:if p(v)>2then ?a$(t):exit for
next:next
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 30 bytes

```powershell
$args|?{$_-match'(.).*\1.*\1'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYpBCsIwEEX3PUUXwVEhBQ8gXkSQkE6SxaQTJimltD17jLpx8eHx30u8oOSARNqyYFXuvlVlxOf9samXjqbYAOfhMlyft8/gqEfXnZTrAQkjTgV6SIEL58CpsWceoQOt4VcFk9LafsvE4mZqSLP3xuN/JehQcLLYdOHIIrx8cTQr1Dc)

Or 40 bytes without a regex: [`$args|?{($_|% t*y|group|%{$_|% c*})-ge3}`](https://tio.run/##TYpBDoMgEADvvsIDdlsTTj03fUpDcFkO6JIVYwz4dkrspbfJzETeUVaPIWjLglW5V67KCK3lne/qU4Y@jUch4S2WIV/CjudDEz7PenbdTbkeMOCMS4IeoufEq@fYmJgn6EBr@F3exHg0bzmwuC00DBuRIfy/BB0KLhZbTjyzCO8XTuaA@gU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>62</s> 35 bytes

```arturo
$=>[select&=>[tally&|some?=>[&>2]]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?ELRdsF)

-27 due to 0.9.82 introducing `tally`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.7](http://julialang.org/), 37 bytes

```julia
!l=l[l.|>i->any(count.([i...],i).>2)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4xb8IwFIR3fsUjDI6lYAmWSpEStWVj7Rh5cI1xXDl@luOIRuK/B1zA6nb33nen@5msEbvfZQPHpGDH3kDi4EVcfYpRMYmTi6Ws60MvQgVjXX98jzEIGb9iME5TaODBNE0p6Z2gy9o2trPs2pptK9xc/v1Z2RnGGK8MZe2e8uV97PEC665QVg3KxaKCwvcY8X73yWjEU8E3sG2hI0@IVEAyRPgql/TC@zmlJFoM58kmbSethVa55On/54I6q6CcVImPOGAIeHnok5hzMmNpwAsjHJYb)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$10\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 8.23 bytes

```
gz:zy.L2>S
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhar0qusqir1fIzsgiECUPEFN5Wi1YtS01KLUvOSU9V1FNRL8nPzi4ryyyHslMRK9ViIUgA)

```python
gz:zy.L2>S  # Implicit input
g           # Filter the input for items where:
         S  #  There is at least one item where:
     .L     #   The lengths of
 z:zy       #   The string, sorted and grouped
       2>   #   Is greater than 2
            # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 100 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBBT8MwDIXv/RVWTwlCkeBYaZPgzE4TXBCqstbtgpI4OOlGQfvtJdlA4gA3P7/vWbZjp61ejAvECWIRqiNrsUuGvDLOTUnvLKoHE9NGh6qi3Ws2YaONh88KoMcBXBZC8xgbuGPW8/M2sfHji2zg0ZsEqzMJEHI3WS9YlHGiRosOfaqvoQ57ShT3FIoYifpaSvlnaK9DmAuV9yQeJltqO42jHvHfEOOAjL7DAidyxEzHS93r@Tt2qqqDtsBNyfzcsFr/VrBaWjUYm5DF8WLlr4ijGpmmcD8L0@eDTJqlcjo8aTthFK2K5gOlSrTFNxXzpzPYqvZGNu2VVIczpfA9D8vw@lbK5bR8AQ)

```scala
_.filter(w=>ListMap(w.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).toSeq.sortBy(_._1):_*).values.exists(_>2))
```