# Negative XOR primes

Tags: code-golf, number, primes, base-conversion, abstract-algebra

About a year ago you were asked to find the [XOR primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66911/56656).  These are numbers whose only factors are 1 and themselves when performing [XOR multiplication in base 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50240/56656).  Now were are going to spice things up a bit.

We are going to find the XOR primes in base *-2*

### Converting to Base -2

Base -2 is a lot like every other base.  The left most place is the 1s place (1 = (-2)<sup>0</sup>), next to that its the -2s place (-2 = (-2)<sup>1</sup>), next to that is the 4s place (4 = (-2)<sup>2</sup>), and so on and so forth.  The big difference is that negative numbers can be represented in base -2 without any negative sign.

Here are some example conversions:

```
Decimal | Base -2
-----------------
 6      |   11010
-7      |    1001
 12     |   11100
-15     |  110001
```

### XOR addition in Base -2

XOR addition in Base -2 is pretty much the same as XOR addition in binary.  You simply convert the number to Base -2 and XOR each digit in place.  (This is the same as addition without the carry)

Here is an example worked through step by step:

*(We will use the symbol `+'` to indicate Base -2 XOR addition)*

Start in base 10:

```
6 +' 19
```

Convert to base -2:

```
11010 +' 10111
```

Add them without carrying:

```
   11010
+' 10111
---------
   01101
```

Convert your result back into base 10:

```
-3
```

### XOR multiplication in Base -2

Once again XOR multiplication in base -2 is nearly the same as XOR multiplication in binary.  If you are not familiar with XOR multiplication in base 2 there is an excellent explanation [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50240/56656) I suggest you take a look at that first.

XOR multiplication in Base -2 is the same as performing long multiplication in base -2 except when it comes to the last step instead of adding up all of the numbers with a traditional `+` you use the `+'` we defined above.

Here is an example worked out below:

Start in decimal:

```
8 *' 7
```

Convert to Base -2:

```
11000 *' 11011
```

Set up long division:

```
   11000
*' 11011
---------
```

Multiply the first number by every place in the second

```
      11000
*'    11011
------------
      11000
     11000
        0
   11000
  11000
```

Add up all the results using base -2 XOR addition

```
       11000
*'     11011
-------------
       11000
      11000
         0
    11000
+' 11000
-------------
   101101000
```

Convert the result back to decimal:

```
280
```

## The challenge

Your challenge is to verify whether or not a number is an XOR prime in base -2.   A number is an XOR prime in base -2 if the only pair of integers that multiply to it in base are 1 and itself.  (1 is not prime)

You will take in a number and output a boolean, truthy if the input is an XOR prime in base -2 falsy otherwise.

Solutions will be scored in bytes with attaining the lowest number of bytes as the goal.

## Test cases

The following are all XOR primes in base -2:

```
-395
-3
-2
 3
 15
 83
```

The following are *not* XOR primes in base -2:

```
-500
-4
 0
 1
 258
 280
```

Comment: `258` seems to equal `-2 *' -129 = 10 *' 10000011`

Comment: @JungHwanMin my bad that one was supposed to be in the other category.  I apologize if this has caused you any trouble.

Comment: In your addition example `6 +' -19` you actually use `19` not `-19`.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>156</s> 101 bytes

```
IrreduciblePolynomialQ[FromDigits[{#}//.{a_,p___}/;a!=1&&a!=0:>{-⌊a/2⌋,a~Mod~2,p},x],Modulus->2]&
```

As stated [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50240/60043), this works because XOR multiplication is essentially multiplication in the polynomial ring F_2.

**Explanation**

```
{#}//.{a_,p___}/;a!=1&&a!=0:>{-⌊a/2⌋,a~Mod~2,p}
```

Start with `{input}`. Repeatedly replace a number `a` (except 0 and 1) by `a` mod 2 and prepend -floor(`a`/2), until it does not change. This calculates the input in base -2.

```
FromDigits[ ... ,x]
```

Create a polynomial using the digits of the base -2 number, using `x` as the variable. e.g. `{1, 1, 0}` -> `x^2 + x`

```
IrreduciblePolynomialQ[ ... ,Modulus->2]
```

Check whether the resulting polynomial is irreducible, with modulus 2.

**Old version (156 bytes)**

```
If[#==1,1,Outer[FromDigits[BitXor@@(#~ArrayPad~{i++,--l}&)/@Outer[i=0;l=m;1##&,##],-2]&,k=Tuples[{0,1},m=Floor@Log2[8Abs@#~Max~1]]~Drop~{2},k,1,1]]~FreeQ~#&
```

**List of primes**

[Here's a list of base -2 XOR primes between -1000 and 1000 (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/HcdwNCJd)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 36 bytes

```apl
{2=≢⍸⍵=∘.{¯2⊥≠/⊤⍺×2*⍸⌽⊤⍵}⍨1+⍳8×1+|⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/6uNbB91LnrUu@NR71bbRx0z9KoPrTd61LX0UecC/UddSx717jo83UgLJN@zF8zfWvuod4Wh9qPezRaHpxtq14BE/qcBzXrU2/eoq/nQeuNHbROB5gcHOQPJEA/P4P9ph1YoAMWB2EjBWMHQFMgw5IIImigYKBgqGCmYAAA)

Simple brute-force, and extremely inefficient (input 15 takes ~1s). Given an integer `n`, it generates a range large enough that their binary representation evaluated in negabinary includes `n`, evaluates its multiplication table (last step evaluated to negabinary instead of binary), then checks if the input appears exactly twice.

The algorithm was inspired by [a solution to regular XOR primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66963/78410).

#### How it works

```apl
{2=≢⍸⍵=∘.{¯2⊥≠/⊤⍺×2*⍸⌽⊤⍵}⍨1+⍳8×1+|⍵}  ⍝ Inline function; ⍵←n
                             8×1+|⍵   ⍝ 8×(1+abs(n))
                          1+⍳         ⍝ 1-based range of above
       ∘.{              }⍨  ⍝ Evaluate XORmul table
                      ⊤⍵    ⍝ Binary of right arg
                  2*⍸⌽      ⍝ Digit values of ones
               ⊤⍺×          ⍝ Multiply left arg and convert each to binary
             ≠/             ⍝ Digit-wise XOR
          ¯2⊥               ⍝ Interpret as negabinary and convert to integer
 2=≢⍸⍵=  ⍝ Does n appear exactly twice in the table?
```