# Find the program that prints this integer sequence (Robbers' thread)

Tags: number, sequence, cops-and-robbers

**This is the robbers' thread. The cops' thread goes [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77419/find-the-program-that-prints-this-integer-sequence-cops-and-robbers).**

In the cops thread, the task was to write a program/function that takes a positive (or non-negative) integer and outputs/returns another number (not necessarily integer). The robbers task is to unscramble the code the cops used to produce this output.

The cracked code doesn't have to be identical, as long as it has the same length and any revealed characters are in the correct positions. The language must also be the same (version numbers can be different). The output must of course be identical.

**No-ops can be used in robber's solution.**

The winner of the robbers thread will be the user who has cracked the 
most submissions by May 7th 2016. If there's a tie, the user who has cracked submissions with the longest combined code will win.

The submission should be formatted like this:

## Language, nn characters (including link to answer), Cop's username

Code:

```
function a(n)
    if n<2 then
        return n
    else
        return a(n-1) + a(n-2)
    end
end
```

Output

```
a(0) returns 0
a(3) returns 2
```

Optional explanation and comments.

Comment: These rules here are different from the cops thred, where it says: *However, any proposed source code that produces the same set of output also counts as valid, as long as it is also found in OEIS.*

Comment: What happens if the examples match multiple OEIS series ? This Just happened with Adnan and me

Comment: @FliiFe Under the current rules, any code which matches the cop's code and outputs an OEIS sequence whose values coincide with the cop's examples is a valid crack.

Comment: Has this finished? Is there a winner?

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL, 5 bytes, Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77454/24877)

```
H5-*|
```

This code calculates `abs((2-5)*input)` which is just `a(n)=3*n` for positive numbers, which is http://oeis.org/A008585

Comment: Well done! My original code was `35B*s` :-)

Answer (score 5):

### [Hexagony](https://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony), [7 bytes, Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77442/8478), [A005843](https://oeis.org/A005843)

```
?{2'*!@
```

or

```
 ? {
2 ' *
 ! @
```

[Try it online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=P3syJyohQA&input=Mg)

Simply doubles the input (and assumes positive input). The code is (for once) simply executed in reading order. The code uses three memory edges *A*, *B*, *C* with the memory pointer starting out as shown:

[image]

```
?    Read integer from STDIN into edge A.
{    Move memory pointer forwards to edge B.
2    Set edge B to 2.
'    Move memory pointers backwards to edge C.
*    Multiply edges A and B and store result in C.
!    Print result to STDOUT.
@    Terminate program.
```

Comment: The exact same with what I had! :)

Comment: @KennyLau I think the solution is unique up to swapping the roles of `B` and `C`.

Answer (score 4):

## [J, 7 bytes, Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77425)

#### Code

```
2+*:@p:
```

#### Output

```
   f =: 2+*:@p:
   f 0
6
   f 2
27
```

Try it with [J.js](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=(%202%2B*%3A%40p%3A%20)%202).

#### How it works

Sequence [A061725](http://oeis.org/A061725) is defined as **a(n) := p<sub>n</sub>² + 2**, where **p<sub>n</sub>** is the **(n + 1)<sup>th</sup>** prime number.

```
2+*:@p:  Monadic verb. Argument: n

    @    Atop; combine the verbs to the right and to the left, applying one after
         the other.
     p:  Compute the (n+1)th prime number.
  *:     Square it.
2+       Add 2 to the result.
```

Comment: Nice job! You understand the code more than I did XD

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), [5 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77459), [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan), [A001788](http://oeis.org/A001788)

```
Læ€OO
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=TMOm4oKsT08&input=NQ) This uses an alternative definition given on the page. Explanation:

```
Læ€OO
L     range;      [1..n]
 æ    powerset;   [[], [1], ..., [1..n]]
  €O  mapped sum; [0, 1, ..., T(n)]
    O sum;        [a(n)]
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, [10 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77515/41859), [user81655](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46855/user81655), [A033999](http://oeis.org/A033999)

*<s>I think</s> I got it. Yeah.* This one was really hard. I like the submission because it relies heavily on precedences.

---

It's the sequence [A033999](http://oeis.org/A033999):

> a(n) = (-1)^n.

**Source**

```
t=>~t.z**t
```

**Explanation**

If you split this code according to the [JavaScript operator precedences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) you get:

1. `.` (precedence *18*) gets evaluated first and `t.z` will return `undefined`.
2. `~` (precedence *15*) tries to cast `undefined`, resulting in `0`, and returns `-1` after bitwise not.
3. `**` (precedence *14*) will return `-1 ^ t`, where `t` is *odd* or *even*, resulting in `-1` or `1`.

**Demo**

```
console.log(
    (t=>~t.z**t)(0),
    (t=>~t.z**t)(1),
);
```

[Try before buy](https://jsfiddle.net/cshpjre5/)

---

I will award a 100 rep bounty on this cool Cop submission.

Comment: You are correct, congratulations! :)

Comment: I consider myself well-versed in javascript, but I have _no idea_ how this works.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I've added an explanation. Hopefully it explains it well enough.

Comment: That's why the brute-force didn't find it. I used a transpiler with wrong op precedence >_<

Answer (score 3):

## [Element](https://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element), [7 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77437/48934), [PhiNotPi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2867/phinotpi), [A000042](http://oeis.org/A000042)

```
_'[,1`}
```

Notes: I was misled by the `}` for soooooo long. So it also matches `[`.

[Try it online!](http://element.tryitonline.net/#code=XydbLDFgfQ&input=Mw)

---

#### How it works:

```
_'[,1`}
_        main_stack.push(input());
 '       control_stack.push(main_stack.pop());
  [      Object temp = control_stack.pop();
         for(int i=0;i<temp;i++){
   ,         Object a = main_stack.pop(); //is actually zero
             main_stack.push(a.toChars()[0]);
             main_stack.push(a);
    1        main_stack.push(1);
     `       System.out.println(main_stack.pop());
      }  }
```

Comment: Nice! I was trying this, but I couldn't figure out how to get the `,` to stop breaking things.

Comment: My trick was to do `,$` to produce a 1, which gave me an excuse to put the really confusing `,` operator in my program.

Comment: I was stuck at the `}` for tooooo long :(

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), [4 bytes, Paul Picard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77443/34388), [A001317](https://oeis.org/A001317)

Code:

```
$Fx^
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=JEZ4Xg&input=OA)

Explanation:

```
$      # Pushes 1 and input
 F     # Pops x, creates a for-loop in range(0, x)
  x    # Pops x, pushes x and 2x
   ^   # Bitwise XOR on the last two elements
       # Implicit, ends the for-loop
       # Implicit, nothing has printed so the last element is printed automatically
```

The sequence basically is a binary Sierpinski triangle:

```
f(0)=      1                    =1
f(1)=     1 1                   =3
f(2)=    1 0 1                  =5
f(3)=   1 1 1 1                 =15
f(4)=  1 0 0 0 1                =17
```

And translates to the formula **a(n) = a(n - 1) XOR (2 × a(n - 1))**

Luckily, I remembered [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67503/34388) :)

Comment: And it is the exact same one, indeed :D

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, [41 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77448), [insertusernamehere](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41859/insertusernamehere), [A079978](http://oeis.org/A079978)

```php
echo/* does n%3=0 */$argv[1]%3<1?1:0    ;
```

Returns 1 if its argument is a multiple of 3, and 0 otherwise. Not much beyond that.

Comment: Kudos! [I had something completely different in mind](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77448/41859). :)

Answer (score 3):

## Jolf, [3 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77482), [Easterly Irk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46271/easterly-irk), [A001477](https://oeis.org/A001477)

```
axx
```

Consists of a simple cat (`ax`) followed by a no-op. Not sure what the cop was going for here.

Comment: That is most definitely _not_ the identity function. It's alert the input. There are actual identity functions :P

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), [9 bytes, beaker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77493/34388), [A022844](https://oeis.org/A022844)

Code (with a whitespace at the end):

```
3x2xYP*k
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=M3gyeFlQKmsg&input=MTI)

Found the following three matches with a script I wrote:

```
Found match: A022844
info: "name": "Floor(n*Pi).",

Found match: A073934
info: "name": "Sum of terms in n-th row of triangle in A073932.",

Found match: A120068
info: "name": "Numbers n such that n-th prime + 1 is squarefree.",
```

I tried to do the first one, which is basically done with `YP*k`:

```
3x2x       # Push 3, delete it, push 2 and delete that too
    YP     # Push pi
      *    # Multiply by implicit input
       k   # Floor function
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Java, 479 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77487/52921), [Daniel M.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/41505/), [A000073](https://oeis.org/A000073)

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class A{

    public static int i=0;
    public boolean b;

    static A a = new A();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int input = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        LinkedList<Integer> l = new LinkedList<>();
        l.add(1);
        l.add(0);
        l.add(0);

        for(int ix = 0; ix<=input; ix++)if(ix>2){
            l.add(0,l//d
            .get(1)+l.peekFirst()+     l.get(2));
        }

        System.out.println(input<2?0:l.pop()
              +(A.i        +(/*( 5*/ 0 )));
    }
}
```

If you miss non-revealed characters, they are replaced with spaces.

Comment: Very different from the original code, but still, congrats!

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, [38 bytes, histocrat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77588/45268), [A008592](http://oeis.org/A008592)

```
->o{(s="+o++o"*5).sum==03333&&eval(s)}
```

Could be different from the intended solution as I found this by hand.

Comment: Nicely done! Intended solution was similar: `"+f+=f"*5`.

Answer (score 3):

## [S.I.L.O.S](http://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), [betseg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96814/47066), [A001844](http://oeis.org/A001844)

```
readIO
a=i
a+1
i*2
i*a
i+1
printInt i
```

[Try it online!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=cmVhZElPCmE9aQphKzEKaSoyCmkqYQppKzEKcHJpbnRJbnQgaQ&input=&args=NQ)

Comment: goddamnit you ninjad me

Answer (score 2):

## Jolf, [5 characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77421/48934), [Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/c%e1%b4%8f%c9%b4%e1%b4%8f%ca%80-ob%ca%80%c9%aa%e1%b4%87%c9%b4), [A033536](http://oeis.org/A033536)

Code:

```
!K!8x
```

Output:

```
a(2) = 8
a(10) = 4738245926336
```

Comment: This was the exact same answer I had. I was about to post it. :(

Comment: Neither answer is the original, but they are functionally the same.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

## [Reng v3.3](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/), [36 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77427/48934), [Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/c%e1%b4%8f%c9%b4%e1%b4%8f%ca%80-ob%ca%80%c9%aa%e1%b4%87%c9%b4), [A005449](http://oeis.org/A005449)

```
iv:#+##->>)2%æ~¡#~
#>:3*1+*^##</div>
```

### Output

```
a(1) = 2
a(3) = 15
```

### Explanation

I completely ignored the prespecified commands, except the `)` because I did not have enough space.

The actually useful commands are here:

```
iv      >>)2%æ~
 >:3*1+*^
```

Stretched to a straight line:

```
i:3*1+*)2%æ~
```

With explanation:

```
i:3*1+*)2%æ~ stack
i            [1]      takes input
 :           [1,1]    duplicates
  3          [1,1,3]  pushes 3
   *         [1,3]    multiplies
    1        [1,3,1]  pushes 1
     +       [1,4]    adds
      *      [4]      multiplies
       )     [4]      shifts (does nothing)
        2    [4,2]    pushes 2
         %   [2]      divides
          æ  []       prints
           ~ []       halts
```

The formula is `a(n) = n(3n+1)/2`.

Comment: +1 for `</div>`, an HTML closing tag that somehow appeared in Reng code.

Comment: @zyabin101 Wrong place?

Comment: Nope. I just like finding hidden secrets in code. :-P

Comment: Well this is in the cop's code, so...

Answer (score 2):

## 05AB1E, [3 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77441/48934), [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan), [A000292](http://oeis.org/A000292)

```
LLO
```

#### Output

```
a(9) = 165
a(10) = 220
```

#### How it works

```
LLO Stack
L   [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]                         range
 L  [1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,...,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] range of range
  O sum all of them
```

The mathematical equivalent is `sum(sum(n))`, where `sum` is `summation`.

Comment: Nice job, that was the exact same solution :)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, [87 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77451), [Sp3000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21487/sp3000), [A083054](http://oeis.org/A083054)

```python
n=input()
_=int(3**.5*n)-3*int(n/3**.5)########################################
print _
```

Not that hard, actually. Just searched for sequences that met the constraints until I found one that could be generated in the given space.

Answer (score 2):

## Jolf, 11 bytes, [QPaysTaxes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77429/31957), [A000005](http://oeis.org/A000005)

```
aσ0xxdxxxxx
```

Simple enough: `a`lert the `σ0` (number of divisors of) `x`, then put useless stuff at the end.

[Try it online!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=Yc-DMHh4ZHh4eHh4&input=MTAKCjIwCgozMA) The test suite button's a bit broke, but still shows proper results.

(You could've golfed it down to two bytes! Just `σ0` would've done nicely.)

Comment: Wow! Le builtins minuscules! +1

Comment: This is nothing like what I had, but it sure works. Mine was so long because you didn't have any mention of finding divisors in the docs.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I guess I need to update the docs :P But seriously, just Ctrl+F the source code ;)

Comment: I put my original code in my question if you wanna see it. In retrospect, I should have showed different characters :P

Answer (score 2):

## [Jolf](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf), [11 bytes, RikerW](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77486/34388), [A011551](https://oeis.org/A011551)

Code:

```
c*mf^+91x~P
```

Explanation:

```
     +91     # add(9, 1) = 10
    ^   x    # 10 ** input
  mf         # floor function (no-op)
 *       ~P  # multiply by phi
c            # ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

[Try it here](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=YyptZl4rOTF4flA&input=MTI).

Comment: `c` is "cast to integer"

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), [119 bytes, Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77461/46855), [A178501](http://oeis.org/A178501)

```js
x=>(n="=>[[["|x|"##r(###f#n###;##")|n?Math.pow("#<1##].c####t.##pl##[####nc#"|10,"y([###(###(#]###)"|x-1|``):0|`#h####`
```

I'm sure the actual code generates a trickier sequence than this, but with just the two outputs, this OEIS sequence is simple and matches them.

Without all the ignored characters, the algorithm is just `x=>x?Math.pow(10,x-1):0`.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), [5 bytes, Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77502/34388), [A051696](https://oeis.org/A051696)

Code:

```
Ðms!¿
```

Explanation:

```
Ð      # Triplicate input.
 m     # Power function, which calculates input ** input.
  s    # Swap two top elements of the stack.
   !   # Calculate the factorial of input.
    ¿  # Compute the greatest common divisor of the top two elements.
```

So, basically this calculates **gcd(n!, n<sup>n</sup>)**, which is [A051696](https://oeis.org/A051696).

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w5BtcyHCvw&input=Ng).

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, [18 bytes, insertusernamehere](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77508/25180), [A023443](http://oeis.org/A023443)

Code:

```
echo$argv[1]+0+~0;
```

Output:

```
a(0) = -1
a(1) = 0
```

Comment: Very nice approach. My source was slightly different: `echo$argv[1]+-+!0;`. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave (34 bytes) by Stewie Griffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77490/30688)

The sequence is [A066911](http://oeis.org/A066911).

```
@(m)(mod(m,u=1:m  )&isprime(u))*u'
```

Comment: Nice =) For the record, I had `u=0:m-1`. The same sequence.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, [137 bytes, insertusernamehere](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77524/25180), [A000959](http://oeis.org/A000959)

Code:

```
for($s=range(1,303);$i<($t=count($s));$s=array_merge($s))for($j=($k=++$i==1?2:$s[$i-1])-1;$j<$t;$j+=$k )unset($s[$j]);echo$s[$argv[1]-1];
```

Output:

```
a(3)  =   7
a(7)  =  21
a(23) =  99
```

Comment: Nicely done. Your source is [slightly different](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77524/41859) and you even saved one byte. :)

Answer (score 2):

### 05AB1E, [10 bytes, George Gibson](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79936/47066), [A003215](http://oeis.org/A003215)

**Code:**

```
Ds3*s1+*1+
```

**Explanation:**

Computes 3*n*(n+1)+1 which is the oeis sequence A003215.

Answer (score 1):

## [Element](https://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element), [10 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77430/48934), [PhiNotPi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2867/phinotpi), [A097547](http://oeis.org/A097547)

```
2_4:/2@^^`
```

[Try it online!](http://element.tryitonline.net/#code=Ml80Oi8yQF5eYA&input=NA)

### Output

```
a(3) = 6561
a(4) = 4294967296
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyke, [6 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77476), [muddyfish](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32686/muddyfish), [A005563](http://oeis.org/A005563)

```
0QhXts
```

Yay hacks! The `0Qh` and `s` are no-ops. `hXt` just computes `(n + 1) ^ 2 - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

## J, [8 bytes, Kenny Lau](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77506/25180), [A057427](https://oeis.org/A057427)

Code:

```
(-%- )\.
```

Output:

```
a(0) = 0
a(1..29) = 1
```

I don't think this is intended. And I don't know why J had this behavior. But it works.

Comment: Gonna add one more restriction xd

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), [70 bytes, FliiFe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77528/34388), [A070650](https://oeis.org/A070650)

Code (with obfuscated version below):

```
DhbI|qb"#"qb"#"R!1Iqb"#";=^Q6+""s ]%Q27  ;.qlY+Q1Ih+""Z##;.q)=Z+Z1;@YQ
DhbI|qb"#"qb"#"R!1Iqb"#"#####+""s####2###;##lY+Q1Ih+""Z#####)=Z+Z1;@YQ (obfuscated)
```

This basically does:

```
=^Q6%Q27
```

It calculates **a(n) = n<sup>6</sup> % 27**, which is [A070650](https://oeis.org/A070650). Explanation:

```
=^Q6       # Assign Q to Q ** 6
    %Q27   # Compute Q % 27
           # Implicit output
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=DhbI%7Cqb%22%23%22qb%22%23%22R%211Iqb%22%23%22%3B%3D%5EQ6%2B%22%22s+%5D%25Q27++%3B.qlY%2BQ1Ih%2B%22%22Z%23%23%3B.q%29%3DZ%2BZ1%3B%40YQ&input=2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A4&debug=0)

Comment: Oops, that's not the one. I updated my answer with another one

Comment: From the rules, this is valid. Congrats !

Comment: I guess I can tell you the sequence now, It's A007770 (0-indexed)

Comment: @FliiFe Oh, I would never have guessed that :p

Comment: Actually, if you know the sequence, it's easily spottable, but if you don't, it becomes really hard

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 108, [CAD97](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77534/38368), [A005132](https://oeis.org/A005132)

```
def a(n):
 if n == 0: return 0
 f=a(n-1)-n
 return f if f>0 and not f in(a(i)for i in range(n))else a(n-1)+n
```

Obfuscated code :

```
def a(n):
 ###n####0######n#0
 f=a#######
 return f #f#####a###### f ####a(##f###i#i###a####n##else a#######
```

Outputs:

```
>>> a(0)
0
>>> a(4)
2
>>> a(16)
8
>>> a(20)
42
```

Comment: Exactly what I had. Expected it to be easy, honestly.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (71 bytes) by mIllIbyte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77475/30688)

The [sequence](http://oeis.org/A002265) is floor(n/4).

```c
x;f(_){x/=4;
    }
main(){
 scanf("%d",&x);
 f( 6);
 printf("%d", x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3 (58 bytes) by CAD97](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77563/30688)

The sequence is [A062318](http://oeis.org/A062318). There were a lot of unnecessary characters in this one, so I commented some out.

```
a=lambda n: ~-( -~(n%2)
# if ###### else 
*3**(n//2))#)##)
```

Comment: The original was the slightly more literal `a=lambda n:int(3**(n/2)-1 if n%2==0 else 2*3**(n/2-1/2)-1)`, but this works as well and is golfier. GG

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, [11 bytes, histocrat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77602/8478), [A011765](https://oeis.org/A011765)

It only needs 5...

```
->i{i%4/3 }
```

I'd like to note though that the sequence is off-by-one compared to OEIS (which specifies that the first term corresponds to `A(1)`).

Comment: Argh, could've sworn I checked for solutions of that form. Also, sorry, yes, didn't notice the offset on the sequence entry.

Comment: Intended solution: `i[i%2]` (the (i mod 2)th least significant bit of i)

Comment: @histocrat neat, I didn't even know bits could be indexed like that. :)

Answer (score 1):

### [Haskell, 51 bytes, Zgarb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77600/34531), [A063866](https://oeis.org/A063866)

```
f e=sum[1|1<-sum<$>mapM(flip(:)=<<pure.(0-))[1..e]]
```

Output: `map f [0..6]`: `[0,1,1,0,0,3,5]`.

Answer (score 1):

## 05AB1E, [5 bytes, Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77596/25180), [A102669](http://oeis.org/A102669)

Code:

```
TA«-g
```

Output:

```
a(0) = 0
a(1) = 0
a(2) = 1
a(3) = 1
a(4) = 1
a(5) = 1
a(6) = 1
a(7) = 1
a(8) = 1
a(9) = 1
a(10) = 0
a(11) = 0
```

Too bad you have designed the language in this inconvenient way.

Comment: Wow, I did not see that coming haha. The original code was `0K1Kg`.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 17 bytes, [ASCIIThenANSI](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77686/32686), [A000027](https://oeis.org/A000027)

```
def a(n):return n
```

Trivial?

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 60 bytes, [ASCIIThenANSI](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77687/32686) [A000930](https://oeis.org/A000930)

```
def a(n):
 if n<3:
  return 1
 else:
  return a(n-1)+a(n-3)
```

Still trivial

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), [(4 bytes) by Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77693/31849)

The sequence is [A126804](http://oeis.org/A126804), and the code to produce it is

```
D·ŸP
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RMK3xbhQ&input=NA)

I've never even looked at a program in 05AB1E before, it looks like a pretty cool language!

Comment: Very nice! That was the exact same solution :)

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, [45 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77573/48934), [Katenkyo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41019/katenkyo), [A001477](http://oeis.org/A001477)

```
a=function(n)return n-1<1 and 0or 1+a(n-1)end
```

Answer (score 1):

### Swift, 55 bytes, [Nefrin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77523/47066), [A103847](https://oeis.org/A103847)

The sequence is McCarthy's 91 Function.
It takes the value **91** for any **n** up to **101** and then continues with **92,93,94 ...**

I wonder what it's actually useful for.

```
func M(n:Int)->Int{
return(n<=100) ?M(M(n+11)):n-10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 28 bytes, [Lause](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77538/47066), [A256861](https://oeis.org/A256861)

**Code:**

```
DD>D>D>D>****sD<*6+*6n2n5**/
```

**Explanation:**

```
              # implicit n on stack
DD>D>D>D>     # save n,n+1,n+2,n+3,n+4 on the stack
****          # multiply top 5 on stack together
              #     new stack: n,n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)
sD<*          # rotate, duplicate, decrease, multiply
              #     new stack: n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4),n(n-1)
6+*           # add 6 to stack, add top 2, multiply top 2
              #     new stack: n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n(n-1)*6)
6n2n5**       # add 720 to stack
/             # divide
              # implicitly print n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n(n-1)*6)/720
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Jolf, 3 bytes, Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77984/8478), [A091940](https://oeis.org/A091940)

```
+QQ
```

[Test it here.](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/index.html#code=K1FR)

Since the output is off-by-one, the second formula on OEIS reduces to `n + n^4`. Where we implement `n^4` by squaring the input twice.

Comment: Oh, this wasn't it. What does off-by-one mean? I think I messed it up

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ It means that the number you get for `a(23)` is actually `A091940(24)`. But this code matches all 4 test cases in your cop post, so whether or not this was your original code, I think it's a valid crack.

Comment: Okay then. Nice job!

Answer (score 1):

### [05AB1A](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), [4 bytes, Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78009/47066), [A001127](https://oeis.org/A001127)

**Code:**

```
$FÂ+
```

**Explained:**

```
$          # push 1 and input
 F         # input number of times, do:
  Â        # duplicate and reverse
   +       # add
```

The sequence starts at **1** and continues by adding the current number to its reverse.

```
0: 1
1: 1+1 = 2
2: 2+2 = 4
3: 4+4 = 8
4: 8+8 = 16
5: 16+61 = 77
6: 77+77 = 154
7: 154+451= 605
and so on...
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), [3 bytes, Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78508/34388), [A022559](https://oeis.org/A022559)

Code:

```
!ÓO
```

Explanation:

```
!    # Compute the factorial of the implicit input.
 Ó   # Compute the exponents of the prime factors.
  O  # Sum that up together.
```

Resulting into **A022559**. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=IcOTTw&input=Ng)

Answer (score 1):

### [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/), [1 byte, mnbvc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78657/47066), [A004085](https://oeis.org/A004085)

Code:

```
Õ
```

Sequence is the sum of digits of Euler totient function of n.

Answer (score 1):

### LiveCode, [35 bytes, mnbvc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78655/47066), [A001477](https://oeis.org/A001477)

I/O:

```
oeis (0) = 0
oeis (2) = 2
```

Code:

```
function oeis n
    return n*1
End oeis
```

Sequence returns the non-negative integers.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, [37 bytes, mnbvc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78676/47066), [A000290](https://oeis.org/A000290)

I/O:

```
a(2) = 4
a(4) = 16
```

Code:

```
def a(n):
    return n*n#__!______n____*_
```

Sequence return square of input

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), [3 bytes, Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78536/34388), [A002994](https://oeis.org/A002994)

Code:

```
3m¬
```

Explanation:

```
3m   # Compute input ** 3
  ¬  # Take the first digit
```

This gives us the *initial digits of the cubes*, which is [**A002994**](https://oeis.org/A002994).

Uses **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=M23CrA&input=NA).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), [8 bytes, Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78535/34388), [A088666](https://oeis.org/A088666)

Code (with obfuscated version below):

```
4m1s+rT%
___s_r__
```

Explanation:

```
4m         # Compute input ** 4
  1        # Add one to the stack
   s       # Swap the top two elements
    +      # Add the two numbers (result = input ** 4 + 1)
     r     # Reverse the stack
      T    # Add 10
       %   # Modulo
```

This comes down to the formula **a(n)** = **(n<sup>4</sup> + 1) % 10**, which is [**A088666**](https://oeis.org/A088666). I'm excited to see what the original code was.

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=NG0xcytyVCU&input=NA).

Answer (score 0):

### [J, 8 bytes, Kenny Lau](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77514/32014), [A057427](https://oeis.org/A057427)

Code:

```
(>1-*)<.
```

Output:

```
a(0) = 0
a(i) = 1 for 0 < i < 30
```

The sequence is simply `signum(n)`.
The program computes `floor(n) > 1 - signum(floor(n))`, which is `signum(n)` for non-negative integers `n`.

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3, [50 bytes, CAD97](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77554/45941), [A004242](https://oeis.org/A004242)

```py
from math import    *
a=lambda n:ceil(1000*log(n))
```

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/fork/M1MmH0)

Output:

```
a(1) => 0
a(10) => 2303
```

Comment: That was fast (though I honestly did not make it very difficult)

Comment: @CAD97 I got tripped up slightly because originally I was only importing `ceil` from math, because I forgot `log` was in `math` and not `__builtins__`. I liked that trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2 (72 bytes) by Sp3000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77570/30688)

There's an unbelievable amount of sequences starting with 1,2,3,6,9,18 from the 1 element. I was fortunate to find one on the 3rd page where these are the only 6 terms: [Divisors of 18](http://oeis.org/A018251).

```
print[1,#((#y
2,3,6,9,#.####c###6#####16#.
18][#)#131963
~-input()#3
]#)
```

Comment: Hmm... I have to say that *is* the right sequence, but I overlooked the idea  that some of the characters could be replaced by newlines (probably got confused due to the rule changes early on). In any case, a crack is a crack.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), [4 bytes, FliiFe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77580/34388), [A000041](https://oeis.org/A000041)

Code:

```
l./Q
```

Explanation:

```
 ./Q  # Calculate the paritions of Q (input)
l     # Take the length, which counts the number of partitions.
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l.%2FQ&input=10&debug=0).

Comment: Now that I think of it, I could have written `l./` with implicit imput.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, [30 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77615/41859), [Aplet123](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52013/aplet123), [A002061](http://oeis.org/A002061)

It's the sequence [A002061](http://oeis.org/A002061):

> Central polygonal numbers: `n^2 - n + 1.`

```
n=>Math.pow(n,!![]+!![])-(n-1)
```

[See it in action on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kw3tajp/).

Answer (score 0):

## Python, [123 bytes, ASCIIThenANSI](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77607/34388), [A089911](https://oeis.org/A089911)

Code:

```
def f(n):
 if n<2:
  return n
 else:
  return f(n-1)+f(n-2)

def g(n):
 if n<2:
  return n
 else:
  return (f(n-1)+f(n-2))%12
```

The formula for this sequence is **g(n) = f(n) % 12**, whereas **f(n)** is the **n<sup>th</sup>** Fibonacci number.

This was actually a really nice puzzle! :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3, 58 bytes, Mega Man](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79055/39462)

```
import math;x=int(input());print(int(x/math.sqrt(5)*x**x))
```

The sequence is:

```
(x/√5)*(x**x)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python, 42 bytes, TùxCräftîñg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95338/12012)

```
def f(x):return x if x<2else f(x-1)+f(x-2)
```

This is the Fibonacci sequence.