# Detecting anagrams within a Parent String

Tags: code-golf, string, permutations

Given two strings, a parent string and a query string respectively, your task is to determine how many times the query string, *or an anagram of the query string*; appears in the parent string, in a case-sensitive search.

Examples of Behaviour

**Input 1**

```
AdnBndAndBdaBn
dAn
```

**Output 1**

```
4
```

**Explanation**
The substrings are highlighted in bold below:

**Adn**BndAndBdaBn

AdnB**ndA**ndBdaBn

AdnBn**dAn**dBdaBn

AdnBnd**And**BdaBn

Note the search MUST be case sensitive for all searches.

**Input 2**

```
AbrAcadAbRa
cAda
```

**Output 2**

```
2
```

This must work for standard ASCII only. This is code-golf, so shortest number of characters will get the tick of approval. Also please post a non-golfed version of your code along with the golfed version.

Comment: Important test case: `abacacaba` `aac`

Comment: Will the parent string always be longer than the query string ?

Comment: Oh very good point! Yes @Optimizer, the parent string will always be longer than the query string.

Comment: @WallyWest What about the additional test case? Should overlapping occurrences of a single permutation be counted?

Comment: Can you give a test case and its correct solution for your most recent comment?

Comment: Can the input be on one line, space seperated?

Comment: @WallyWest, your most recent comment contradicts the question and, as far as I can tell, all seven undeleted answers. I think the only sensible option you have is to delete the comment and to edit the question to be explicit that the substrings *may* overlap.

Comment: @PeterTaylor A valid point... granted, a substring may overlap...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
lfqSzST.:w
```

1 byte golf thanks to @Jakube.

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lfqSzST.%3Aw&input=aa%0Aaaa&debug=0)

Takes the query string, followed by the parent string on a new line.

Ungolfed:

```
z = input()
len(filter(lambda T: sorted(z) == sorted(T), substrings(input())
```

Comment: 1 byte save, simply remove the last character of your solution ;-)

Comment: @Jakube Oh, of course, that's wonderful.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 13 bytes

```
le!lf{\/,(}:+
```

(12 bytes, if overlapping is allowed)

```
l$_,lew:$\e=
```

Input goes like:

```
dAn
AdnBndAndBdaBn
```

i.e.

```
<query string>
<parent string>
```

*Thanks to Dennis for saving 3 bytes in the overlapping scenario*

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=le!lf%7B%5C%2F%2C(%7D%3A%2B&input=dAn%0AAdnBndAndBdaBn)

Comment: You can handle overlapping with the same byte count: `ll1$,ew:$\$e=`

Comment: @Dennis That's really nice. 12 bytes : `l$_,lew:$\e=` But not sure if this would be valid now that OP has said that overlapping is not allowed. Let me see if I can reduce my current one.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>124</s> 118 bytes

[**Try it here**](http://repl.it/oIm/1)

This is an anonymous lambda function. It can probably still be golfed further.

```python
import re,itertools as i
lambda p,q:sum(len(re.findall('(?='+''.join(i)+')',p))for i in set(i.permutations(q,len(q))))
```

Ungolfed:

```python
from itertools import*
import re
def f(p,q):
    c=0
    for i in set(permutations(q,len(q))):
        c+=len(re.findall('(?='+''.join(i)+')',p))
    print c
```

Comment: don't need re, you can just do string.count(substring) for each permutation

Comment: @sirpercival No, string.cound doesn't count overlapping occurrences, like in the `f('aaa','aa')`.

Comment: ah, good call! i forgot about that.

Comment: `import re,itertools as i` saves 6 chars. (I haven't known before that it works.)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, 95 bytes

```js
f=(p,q,n=0,s=a=>[...a].sort().join(''))=>[...p].map((_,i)=>n+=s(p.substr(i,q.length))==s(q))&&n
```

This is a function that takes two arguments like this: `f(parent,query)`.

It goes through all substrings of the parent string of the length of the query string and sorts them. If they are the same as the sorted query string, it increments `n`. Sorting string is annoying because it must be converted to an array, sorted, and converted back to a string. Ungolfed and testable code below.

```js
var f = function(p, q) {
  var n = 0
  var s = function(a) {
    return a.split('').sort().join('')
  }
  
  p.split('').map(function(_, i) {
    n += s(p.substr(i, q.length)) == s(q)
  })
  return n
}

// testing code below
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function() {
  var parent = document.getElementById('parent').value,
    query = document.getElementById('query').value;
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = f(parent, query);
}
```

```html
<label>Parent: <input id="parent" value="AdnBndAndBdaBn"/></label><br />
<label>Query:  <input id="query" value="dAn"/></label><br />
<button id="go">Go</button><br />
<samp id="output">&mdash;</samp> anagrams found
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>77</s> 68 bytes

```
import Data.List
p#s=sum[1|x<-tails p,sort s==sort(take(length s)x)]
```

Usage:

```
*Main> "AdnBndAndBdaBn" # "dAn"
4
*Main> "AbrAcadAbRa" # "cAda"
2
*Main> "abacacaba"# "aac"
2
```

How it works: parent string is `p`, query string is `s`.

`tails` creates a list of it's parameter with successively removing the first element, e.g. `tails "abcd" -> ["abcd","bcd","cd","d",""]`. For every element `x` of this list take a `1` if the sorted first `n` elements (where `n` is the length of `s`) equal the sorted `s`.  Sum the `1`s.

Edit: `tails` instead of explicit recursion

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>76</s> 70 bytes

This lambda function iteratively compares each sorted substring with the target substring. The matches are counted and returned.

```python
lambda a,d:sum(sorted(d[n:n+len(a)])==sorted(a)for n in range(len(d)))
```

The ungolfed code:

```python
f = lambda substr, text: sum(
    sorted(text[n:n+len(substr)]) == sorted(substr)
    for n in range(len(text))
    )

def test(tests):
    for t in tests.split():
        substr, text  = t.split(',')
        print t, f(substr, text)

tests = '''ba,abcba dAn,AdnBndAndBdaBn aac,abacacaba'''
test(tests)
```

and the test output:

```python
ba,abcba 2
dAn,AdnBndAndBdaBn 4
aac,abacacaba 2
```

Comment: ZOUNDS! I never saw that. I will edit and save some bytes. Thanks Jakube.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 61 bytes

```
s=sorted
f=lambda a,b:a>''and(s(b)==s(a[:len(b)]))+f(a[1:],b)
```

This is a recursive algorithm. It checks whether the initial characters of the parent string, once sorted, are the same as the query string, sorted. Then, it recursive on the parent string with its first character removed. It terminates when the parent string is empty.