# Is it a leap year?

Tags: code-golf, date, decision-problem

This challenge is quite simple. You will take an input which will be a year from 1801 to 2400, and output if it is a leap year or not.

Your input will have no newlines or trailing spaces:

```
1954
```

You will output in any way that you like that clearly tells the user if it is or isn't a leap year (I will accept y or n for yes/no)

You can get a list of leap years here: http://kalender-365.de/leap-years.php
I would note that leap years are not ever four years always. 1896 is a leap year, but 1900 is not. The years that follow this "skip" are:

```
1900
2100
2200
2300
```

Test cases:

```
1936 ->  y
1805 ->  n
1900 ->  n
2272 ->  y
2400 ->  y
```

EDIT: This is based on a standard Gregorian calendar: http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/daynumbers-by-year.php

### The Catalogue

The Stack Snippet at the bottom of this post generates the catalogue from the answers a) as a list of shortest solution per language and b) as an overall leaderboard.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
## Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
## Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
## Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the snippet:

```
## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 50798; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 8478; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    else console.log(body);
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() > b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return 1;
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() < b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: left !important;
  display: block !important;
}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/all.css?v=ffb5d0584c5f">
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should be more clear: A given year is a leap year if and only if it is `(divisible by 4)∧((divisible by 100)→(divisible by 400))`.

Comment: *Your input will have no newlines or trailing spaces.* Dang it, that would have saved me 2 bytes...

Comment: You should extend the accepted input range to AD 1601 thru 2400. This covers two 400-year Gregorian cycles (which proleptically start on Monday).

Comment: Does falsy if leap year and truthy if *not* a leap year count as "clearly tells the user if it is or isn't"?

Comment: @lirtosiast I think so. A lot of user assume so.

Answer (score 23):

## APL, <s>16</s> <s>14</s> 12 characters

Returns `0` for a leap year, `1` for a non-leap year.

```
≥/⌽×4 25 4⊤⎕
```

Try this solution on [tryapl.org](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2191%28%u22A2%2C%7B%u2265/%u233D%D74%2025%204%u22A4%u2375%7D%29%A81990+%u237320&run). Note that I have changed the solution to the dfn `{≥/⌽×4 25 4⊤⍵}` as tryapl.com does not support `⎕` (take user input). Note that `⎕` is an empty box, not a missing character.

The same solution in J:

```
4 25 4>:/@|.@:*@#:]
```

### Explanation

Dyadic `⊤` (encode) represents its right argument in the base specified by its left argument. I use base `4 25 4` in this solution. This represents the year *y* as a polynomial

> *y* mod 400 = 100 *a* + 4 *b* + *c* where *b* < 100 and *c* < 4.

Let propositions *α, β,* and *γ* represent if *a,* *b,* and *c* are non-zero: Proposition *γ* is false if *y* is dividable by 4, *β* ∧ *γ* is false if *y* is dividable by 100 and *α* ∧ *β* ∧ *γ*  is false if *y* is dividable by 400.

A truth table (`*` representing “don't care”) were proposition Δ represents if *y* is a leap-year obtains:

```
α β γ | Δ
0 0 0 | 1
1 0 0 | 0
* 1 0 | 1
* * 1 | 0
```

The following statement expresses Δ in *α*, *β*, and *γ*:

> Δ = ¬((*α* → *β*) → *γ*)).

Due to the structure of this statement, one can express ¬Δ as the reduction `≥/⌽α β γ` where ≥ implements ←. This leads to the answer I am explaining right now.

Answer (score 17):

## Javascript (ES6), 21 characters

The standard rule is that `y` is a leap year if 4 divides `y` and if either 100 doesn't divide `y` or 400 does divide `y`. In code,

```
y%4 == 0 && (y%100 != 0 || y%400 == 0)
```

There's no need for that 100 and 400. Instead it suffices to check whether 16 or 4 divides y, with 16 chosen if 25 divides y, 4 otherwise. Golfed, this becomes

```
!(y%(y%25?4:16))
```

A javascript function that implements this is 21 characters long:

```
l=y=>!(y%(y%25?4:16))
```

## Perl, <strike>28</strike> 26 characters

Same idea, but in perl.

```
$_=$_%($_%25?4:16)?"n":"y"
```

Run using the `-lp` options. For example,

```
perl -lpe '$_=$_%($_%25?4:16)?"n":"y"'
```

With the test set as input, this produces

```
1936
y
1805
n
1900
n
2272
y
2400
y
```

Comment: I had used your suggestion in my answer, did not see yours. Now I have rolled back. Note: You should specify EcmaScript 6, or else someone will complain 'not working in Chrome'

Comment: @edc65: Well, he should specify EcmaScript 6 because it *is* EcmaScript 6. Arrow function notation (`y=>...`) is an ES6 feature.

Comment: Shouldn't this be two answers?

Comment: -1 byte: `l=y=>y%(y%25?4:16)<1`

Comment: Save 2 bytes for Perl: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lYlXlUDiI1M7U2sDM007fOslCqV/v83tDQ24zK0MDDlMrQ0MOAyMjI34jIyAbL@5ReUZObnFf/XzSkAAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 16):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
!%|F_jQ*TT4
```

This full program read from STDIN and prints *True* for leap years and *False* otherwise.

*Thanks to @Jakube for suggesting Pyth and basically porting my CJam code.*

Verify the test cases yourself in the [Pyth Compiler/Executor](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m!%25%7CF_jd*TT4.Q&input=1936%0A1805%0A1900%0A2000%0A2100%0A2272%0A2400&debug=0).

#### How it works

```
     jQ*TT   Returns the evaluated input in base 10 × 10.
  |F_        Swaps the digit order and reduces using logical OR.
             So far, we've achieved 1954 -> [19, 54] -> 54 || 19.
!%        4  Returns the logical NOT of the result modulo 4.
             This prints True for multiples of 4 and False otherwise.
```

Answer (score 15):

## CJam, 12 bytes

```
rS+2m<~e|4%!
```

This full program read from STDIN and prints 1 for leap years and 0 otherwise.

Verify the test cases yourself in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=r%7B%3B%0ArS%2B2m%3C~e%7C4%25!%0Ar%7Dh&input=y%201936%0An%201805%0An%201900%0Ay%202000%0An%202100%0Ay%202272%0Ay%202400).

#### How it works

```
r   e# Read from STDIN.
S+  e# Append a space.
2m< e# Rotate two characters to the left.
~   e# Evaluate.
    e# So far, we achieved "1954" -> "54 19" -> 54 19.
e|  e# Logical OR; keep the leftmost non-zero integer.
4%! e# Logical NOT of the kept integer modulo 4.
    e# This pushes 1 for multiples of 4 and 0 otherwise.
```

Comment: I've got a few more 12 byte alternatives. Maybe you can find something in them to bring it down to 11? `r2/~~\e|i4%!`, `r2/~~\~e|4%!`, `r2/:~~\e|4%!`, `r2/S*~\e|4%!` and the 13 byte `r2/:~W%:e|4%!`

Comment: @MartinBüttner: There's also `r2/:i:\e|4%!` (12) and `r2/:i(fe|~4%!` (13). I've even tried GolfScript (which doesn't require `r`), but `or4` is interpreted as a single token. If only the input had a trailing newline...

Answer (score 11):

## TI-BASIC, <s>20 17 16</s> 13

<s>Because it is tokenized, TI-BASIC is often competitive at simple math challenges, but not this one since there is no "divisible" command.</s> Maybe it is after all, but this is still longer than CJam and Pyth.

This uses David Hammond's method.

```
not(fPart(Ans/4/4^not(fPart(sub(Ans
```

Old code at 16 bytes:

```
not(fPart(Ans/16not(fPart(sub(Ansnot(fPart(Ans/4
```

Ungolfed:

```
not(fPart(Ans/16) and not(fPart(Ans/100) and not(fPart(Ans/4))))
```

`fPart(` is "fractional part"; exponentiation has higher precedence than division. In TI-BASIC, close-parens are optional.

I use undocumented behavior of the `sub(` command, usually used to get a substring: when its argument is a number instead of a string, it divides the number by 100. It will work on a TI-83 or 84 series calculator.

20 -> 17 by rearranging code to allow removal of close-parens; 17 -> 16 by replacing 400 with 16; 16 -> 13 by using David Hammond's idea.

Answer (score 10):

## Pyth, <s>19</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
xFm!%Q^d2[2TyT
```

Way too easy. Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=xFm!%25Q%5Ed2%5B2TyT&input=1900&debug=0) or [Test harness](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=QFQ.Qp%22+-%3E+%22Q%0AxFm!%25Q%5Ed2%5B2TyT&input=%22Test+Cases%3A%22%0A1936%0A1805%0A1900%0A2272%0A2400&debug=0)

edit: Missed, that you can print Truthy/Falsy values, instead of `n/y`. -4 byte

edit 2: Used the square root idea of Martin. -1 byte

#### Explanation

```
                 implicit: Q = input number
         [         generate a list with the numbers:
          2          2
           T         10
            yT       2*10 = 20
  m              map each number d to:
   !%Q^d2          not(Q mod d^2) // True if Q % d^2 == 0 otherwise False
xF               fold by xor
```

Answer (score 10):

### Regex, <s>83</s> <s>62</s> 38

Thanks to Toby for tips about combining both halves of the regex.

If we focus on 1801..2400 range only and assume input are integers:

```
(?!00)([02468][048]|[13579][26])(00)?$
```

Test in Ruby (`^` = `\A` and `$` = `\Z` because Ruby) for the desired range:

```
r = /(?!00)([02468][048]|[13579][26])(00)?\Z/
(1801..2401).each do |year|
  leap = year % 4 == 0 && ((year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
  leap_regex = !year.to_s[r].nil?
  if leap != leap_regex
    print 'Assertion broken:', year, " ", leap, " ", leap_regex, "\n"
  end
end
```

---

(Bonus) for something that should work not only for 1801..2400, but for any non-negative year:

```
^\d*(0000|(?!00)([13579][26]|(^|[02468])[048])(00)?)$
```

Test in Ruby (`^` = `\A` and `$` = `\Z` because Ruby) for first 100000 years:

```
r = /\A\d*(0000|(?!00)([13579][26]|(\A|[02468])[048])(00)?)\Z/
100000.times do |year|
  leap = year % 4 == 0 && ((year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
  leap_regex = !year.to_s[r].nil?
  if leap != leap_regex
    print 'Assertion broken:', year, " ", leap, " ", leap_regex, "\n"
  end
end
```

Comment: If you have `(?!)` you can combine the two halves: `(?!00)([02468][048]|[13579][26])(00)?$` - for 38.  That won't work for one-digit years, though.

Answer (score 10):

## Stackylogic, 226 bytes

Yes, that is right. I made a program in Stackylogic (non-TC), which was invented by Helka Homba, for the challenge found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84851/run-stackylogic).

Stackylogic has only binary input, so 10 (or more, any more digits will be ignored) bit binary must be used (least significant bit inputted first). Any dates outside the specified range might fail, as it simply checks what the inputted number is: it doesn't cover unnecessary dates

Not only is this my first challenge with stackylogic, but the first challenge with stackylogic at all.

Get ready for this mess:

```
1
0
1?
010
1?0
010
1?10
?1010
001010
?1010
?1010
?010
?10
?0
0
?
110
?10
11010
?010
11010
?1010
001010
?1010
?1010
?1010
?1010
?010
?0
110
?10
11010
?010
1010
01010
01010
?010
?0
110
?0
110
?0
110
1?0
?10
0?10
?10
?0
01
?
?<
0
```

This took me so long to make, because Stackylogic is the most confusing language I have encountered, and extremely unreadable: you have to know how the rest of the program has executed before you can read the current section being edited. I even had to add spaces for readability while creating it.

### Meagre explanation

This is a simple explanation of what it does.

Stackylogic does not have any mathematical functions, so that made this harder. I had to hardcode most of it, to check if it was a specific number.

First, this program will do a NOR of the least significant bits, discarding them in the process. this means that if it is divisible by 4, it will proceed to the main part of the program, otherwise output 0.

Second, the pointer is carried over to the labyrinth of stackylogic, from here, if the next two bits are zero, it will instantly output 1 (as then it is divisible by 16, and so a leap year despite any other conditions), other wise it will check if it is not any of the numbers that is divisible by 4 but not a leap year, between 1801 and 2400.

To explain in detail, would involve making this post many times longer than it already is

Answer (score 10):

## Haskell, 19 bytes

```haskell
f i=gcd 80i>gcd 50i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00h0zY9OUXBwiDTDkSbGmT@z03MzFOwVchNLPBVKCgtCS4p8slTiC7OyC/XqNRU0NZWUFLQtQMSQBZYME0BKFyjUKlgo6sQbWhhYKCnZ2RiYBAb@x8A)

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (*ES6*) 27

The rule: `(y%4==0) && (y%100!=0 || y%400==0)`

Golfed: `!(y%100<1&&y%400||y%4)` (mainly using [De Morgans's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))

A function implementing the rule:

```js
l=y=>!(y%100<1&&y%400||y%4)
```

A test (run in Firefox) just to be sure:

```js
l=y=>!(y%100<1&&y%400||y%4)

for(o=[],i=0;i<700;i++)
  y=i+1800,
  x=l(y),
  o[i/100|0]=(o[i/100|0]||'')+y+(x?' <b>Y</b>':' <i>N</i>')+'\n'
    
R.innerHTML='<td>'+o.join('</td><td>')+'</td>'
console.log(o[1])
```

```css
td { white-space: pre; font-family: monospace; padding: 8px}

b { color: red; }
i { color: blue; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id=R></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can reduce this by six characters if you use `!(y%(y%25?4:16))` instead of `!(y%100<1&&y%400||y%4)`. For those bothered by the ternary operator, you could use `!(y%(4<<2*!(y%25)))` and still save three characters over   `!(y%100<1&&y%400||y%4)`.

Comment: David Hammen's suggestion is identical to his answer, so I think you should keep the length as 27.

Answer (score 9):

## [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 13 bytes

This one was more interesting than it at first appeared. It took some finagling, but I was finally able to replace those lengthy references to `400` with `4` and the `h` variable (=100).

```
!(a%h?aa/h)%4
```

Outputs `1` for leap year, `0` for non-leap year.  Explanation:

```
               a is command-line argument (implicit)
  a%h?aa/h     If a is divisible by 100, divide it by 100; otherwise, leave it alone
 (        )%4  The result mod 4 is 0 if it's a leap year, nonzero otherwise
!              Negate and (implicitly) print
```

Answer (score 8):

### IBM System Z assembler - 56 bytes.

### (96 bytes of source. Previously <s>712</s> <s>384</s> 202 bytes of source, 168 byte executable).

Smaller version still. No longer saves caller's registers, changes to literal storage, changed addressing mode.

```
 l        CSECT      
         using l,15 
         l  5,y     
         n 5,f      
         bnz r      
         xr 4,4     
         l 5,y      
         d 4,c      
         ch 4,i     
         bne i      
         n 5,f      
         bnz r      
i        dc h'0'    
r        b  *       
y        dc f'2004' 
f        dc f'3'    
c        dc f'100'  
         end
```

New version. This will ABEND with a S0C1 if it's a leap year, and loop if it isn't. Hopefully that fulfils the requirement of indicating the result.

```
l        CSECT             
         ASMDREG           
         SYSSTATE archlvl=2
         IEABRCX  DEFINE   
         save  (14,12)     
         larl  r9,s        
         using s,r9        
         st 13,w+4         
         la 13,w           
         st 13,w+8         
         la 5,2004         
         st 5,y            
         n 5,=f'3'         
         bnz r             
         xr r4,r4          
         l 5,y             
         d r4,=f'100'      
         ch r4,=h'0'       
         bne i             
         n 5,=f'3'         
         bnz r             
i        dc h'0'           
r        b  0              
s        dc 0d'0'          
y        ds f              
w        ds 18f            
         ltorg             
         end
```

OK, so not the shortest (although it might be once we look at the actual executed code plus the interpreter size...)

```
leapyear CSECT                                                
         ASMDREG                                              
         SYSSTATE archlvl=2                                   
         IEABRCX  DEFINE                                      

         save  (14,12)                                        

         larl  r9,staticArea                                  
         using staticArea,r9                                  
         st r13,w_savea+4       .Save callers savearea        
         la r13,w_savea         .Address my savearea          
         st r13,w_savea+8         . and save it               

         open  (O,OUTPUT)             .open file              

         la r5,1936             .r5 = input year              
         st r5,years            .Save year                    

         cvd r5,double          .Convert year to p-decimal    
         mvc edarea,=xl8'4020202020202120' .Move in edit mask 
         ed edarea,double+4      .Make packed decimal year printable                              
         mvc outrec(4),edarea+4  .Move year string to output area                             
         bas r10,isitleap       .Call leap year routine       

         close (O)              .Close files            
         b return               .Branch to finish

isitleap ds 0h                                                      
         mvi outrec+5,c'N'      .Set default value                                   
         n r5,=f'3'             .Are last 2 bits 0 (Divisible by 4)?
         bnz notleap            .No - not leap                      
         xr r4,r4               .Clear R4                           
         l r5,years             .Reload r5 with year                
         d r4,=f'100'           .divide r4/r5 pair by 100           
         ch r4,=h'0'            .Remainder 0?                       
         bne isleap             .No - leap year                     
         n r5,=f'3'             .Quotient divisible by 4?           
         bnz notleap            .No - not leap                      

isleap   ds    0h                                                   
         mvi outrec+5,c'Y'      .Move in leap year indicator                                    

notleap  ds    0h                                                   
         put O,outrec           .Print output record                                    
         br r10                 .Return to caller                   

* Program termination                                               
return   ds 0h                                                      
         l r13,w_savea+4         .Restore callers savearea          
         return (14,12),,rc=0    .Restore registers and return    
* storage areas                                                     
staticarea  dc 0d'0'                                                
outrec      ds cl10                                                 
years       ds f                                                    
w_savea     ds 18f                save area                         
edarea      ds cl8                    .edit area                    
double      ds d                                                    
* Macros and literals                                               
         print nogen                                                
O        dcb   recfm=F,lrecl=6,dsorg=PS,ddname=O,macrf=PM           
         print gen                                                  
*                                                                   
         ltorg                         literal storage              
         end
```

Output:

ABEND S0C1 for a leap year, S222 (when the CPU time has run out) if not.

<s>1936 Y
    1805 N 
    1900 N
    2272 Y
    2400 Y</s>

(when run multiple times)

Comment: Down to 376 bytes by making storage areas minimum size (13 bytes), removing staging area 'leapflag' and only including a single year (rather than 5) in the program.

Comment: 384 bytes by providing a slightly formatted output:

Comment: +1 for interesting and educational choice of language.  :-)

Comment: I could save a few bytes by abandoning convention and not bothering to save the callers registers at the start, seeing as the program never returns to the caller. This is Very Bad Form.

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
q~[YAK]f{2#%!}:^
```

Gives `1` (truthy) for leap years and `0` (falsy) otherwise.

[Run all test cases here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7BS%2F0%3D%3AQ%3B%0A%0AQ~%5BYAK%5Df%7B2%23%25!%7D%3A%5E%0A%0A%5DoNo%7D%2F&input=1936%20-%3E%20%20y%0A1805%20-%3E%20%20n%0A1900%20-%3E%20%20n%0A2000%20-%3E%20%20y%0A2100%20-%3E%20%20n%0A2272%20-%3E%20%20y%0A2400%20-%3E%20%20y%20)

### Explanation

```
q~                 e# Read and eval input.
  [YAK]            e# Push an array containing 2, 10, 20 (the square roots of the
                   e# relevant divisors).
       f{    }     e# Map this block onto that array, also passing in the input year.
         2#        e# Square the divisor.
           %!      e# Modulo followed by logical negation. Gives 1 if the year is divisible
                   e# by the given divisor and 0 otherwise.
                   e# At this point we have one of the following arrays:
                   e#   [0 0 0] - not a leap year
                   e#   [1 0 0] - a leap year
                   e#   [1 1 0] - not a leap year
                   e#   [1 1 1] - a leap year
              :^   e# Reduce XOR onto this array, which gives 1 if there is an odd number
                   e# of 1s and 0 if there's an even number.
```

Answer (score 7):

## R, 29

```R
!(Y=scan())%%4&Y%%100|!Y%%400
```

Test run

```R
> !(Y=scan())%%4&Y%%100|!Y%%400
1: 1936
2: 1805
3: 1900
4: 2272
5: 2400
6: 2200
7: 
Read 6 items
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, <s>40</s> 27 bytes, 17 chars

```
#∣4∧(#∣100<U+F523>#∣400)
```

Uses 17 chars, but 27 bytes. Thanks to @alephalpha for the tip. Note that the vertical bars are actually U+2223 for divides. The `<U+F523>` should be replaced with the corresponding character.

Comment: This is one of those puzzles where Mathematica offers a solution that feels kind of cheaty: LeapYearQ[#]&

Comment: You can use `∣` to represent `Divisible` : `#∣4&&(!#∣100||#∣400)&`, 21 characters, 27 UTF-8 bytes.

Comment: @zeldredge Still, that's not shorter than the APL solution.

Comment: @alephalpha Alternatively, you could use `U+F523` (`\[Implies]`) to make it `#∣4&&(#∣100<U+F523>#∣400)&` for 19 chars (but still 27 bytes).

Comment: This is a standard loophole; you're using a function that does exactly the required functionality. This is verboten.

Comment: @FUZxxl Thanks, it's been a long time since I've read them.

Answer (score 5):

## sed, 55

```
s/00$//
y/0123456789/yNnNyNnNyN/
/N.$/y/ny/yn/
s/.\B//g
```

- First line divides exact centuries by 100.
- Second line gives 'N' to odd digits, 'y' to 4s, and 'n' to non-4s.
- Third line swaps 'y' and 'n' if there's an odd penultimate digit (because 10 is 2 mod 4)
- Final line deletes all but the last character

Note that non-leap years may be printed as `n` or `N` depending on whether they are even or odd.  I consider this a creative interpretation of the rule which allows alternatives to 'yes' and 'no' without specifying that they have to be consistent.

Comment: Extremely clever! [tio your code](https://tio.run/##JcghEoAwDERRn3Ng6W4ClNZygJ4ACYOr6SBy@gKD@E/8dh7jVe/eG8gBEAfVpnmJa8rwUssfBCUMcFSHV0hD2Dfg6l0TF9FMiukHXzTl@L4pitlqYjP5AA)

Answer (score 5):

## C, 81

I can do shorter, but this one neatly sticks to 'char' types, without parsing the argument (e.g. with `atoi`):

```c
main(c,v)char**v;{char*p=*v+9;p-=2*(96==*p+p[1]);putchar("ynnn"[(2**p^p[1])&3]);}
```

It must be invoked with a name 4 characters long, because it makes the standard assumption that arguments immediately follow the program name, separated by NULs.  Furthermore, it assumes that the single argument is encoded in ASCII and has no leading space.

#### Explanation:

```c
main(c,v)
char**v;
{
    char *p = *v+9;
    if (p[0] + p[1] == '0'+'0')
        p -= 2;
    putchar("ynnn"[((*p << 1) ^ p[1])&3]);
}
```

`*v+9` is the position of the 'tens' digit in `v[1]+2`.

If the 'tens' and 'units' characters add to 96, we end in `00`, so back up two characters, so that 'tens' and 'units' point to the century number.

Now xor 'units' with twice the 'tens', mod 4.  This works because `10==±2 mod 4`, so the lower bit of the 'tens' can just toggle bit 1 of the 'units'.  We use the result as an index into our remainders table, printing `y` only if the modular result is zero.

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, <s>30</s> 28 bytes

```rb
y->(y%4<1&&y%100>0)||y%400<1
```

This creates an unnamed function that accepts an integer argument and returns a boolean value. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=y->...`.

Ungolfed:

```rb
function f(y)
    (y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0) || y % 400 == 0
end
```

Example:

```rb
julia> for y in [1936, 1805, 1900, 2272, 2400] println(f(y)) end
true
false
false
true
true
true
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python2 - 37 bytes

```py
g=lambda x:(x%4or x%400and x%100<1)<1
```

Note that if `a` is a nonnegative integer, then `a<1` is a short way of writing `not bool(a)`.  The last `<1` thus effectively converts the expression in the parentheses to a boolean and negates the result.

Applying the function `g` to an integer `n` between 1801 and 2400 will return `True` if `n` is a leap year, and `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ọ4,25>/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7l4THSNTO/3/R/coHG5/1LRGwf3/f0NLYzMdBUMLA1MgaWlgoKNgZGRuBCRNDAwA)

#### How it works

```
ọ4,25>/  Main link. Argument: n (1801 - 2400)

ọ4,25    Test how many times n is divisible by 4 and 25.
     >/  Verify that the order of 4 is higher than the order of 25.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Befunge](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge)-98, (41 bytes)

```
&:4%#v_:aa*%#v_28*%|
"y",;<;@,"n";>;  ;#[
```

Simplicity is awesome.

Answer (score 4):

## C, <s>37</s> <s>34</s> 30 bytes

```c
l(y){y=y%(y%25?4:16)?110:121;}
```

[Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Fvx8dtPJaRnlWpa2)

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 37 bytes

```
def c(s):return s%16*(s%25<1)<(s%4<1)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>49</s> <s>45</s> <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```java
n->n%(n%25<1?16:4)<1
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hc2/DoIwEAbwnae4xaQMEIqAIqhPIAujcSgFTbEcBAqJMTw7Fv@MhuWSu@@X@0o2MKvM7xOXrOvgxAQ@DQCBqmivjBeQzCtAVteyYAic6AjQjPR1NPToFFOCQwIIe5jQOuCK4Mr1Y3qkwc4zYzpFs2v6TGr35UMtcqh0GUlVK/B2vgAzP03po1NFZde9shsdKYkEbU5ouA7Md@1/snX8JRI6zgJx3Y27RLzfl9EYpxc)

Some **22 bytes solutions:**

```java
n->n%25<1?n%16<1:n%4<1
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY27DoJAEEV7vmIaEigg7AoogvoF0lAai3VBswizBBYSY/h2XHyUhmaSO/fMnJINzCnz@8Qr1nVwZAKfBoBAVbRXxgtI5whwkbIqGAK3dAVox3o7Gnp0iinBIQWEHUzo7NGkQUIOaJIwIVs0/YRM8Uw2/aXS5PdgkCKHWuusTLUCb6czMPvjyh6dKmpX9sptdKUqtNDlFolWof0W/0c2XrCERJ63gFC6pkuI//syGuP0Ag)

```java
n->(n%25<1?n%16:n%4)<1
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY27DoJAEEV7vmIakt0CAggogvoF0lAai3VBswgDYRcSY/h2XHyUhmaSO/fMnJINzCrz@8QrJiUcmcCnASBQFd2V8QLSOQJcmqYqGAInugKksd6Ohh5SMSU4pICwgwmtPUHTCxL3gKYbbtH0aeJO8Uy2/aXS5PdgaEQOtdaRTHUCb6czMPpxZQ@pitpuemW3ulIVErQ5caNVSN/i/8jGCZaQyHEWEM9be0uI//syGuP0Ag)

```java
java.time.Year::isLeap
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY3LDoIwEEX3fMUsy8IG8QnEP1A2rIxxMdRqiqUltJAYw7fX4mNp2Ewyc8/cU2GPs@pyd0yiMXBAoZ4BgFCWt1dkHPJxBSi1lhwVMOIjUGHmr0Pgh7FoBYMcFOzAVb6OWlFzeuTYpqkwe46Ny0ay6Urpye9Dr8UFaq8jhW2Fup3OgOHHVTyM5TXVnaWNj6xURFFG5sliHb7F/5FttJpCkiiaQOJ4E08hy1/LEAzuBQ)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->                // Method with integer parameter and boolean return-type
   n%          <1  //  Return whether the integer is divisible by:
     (n%25<1?      //   If the input is divisible by 25:
             16    //    Check if its divisible by 16
            :      //   Else:
             4)    //    Check if its divisible by 4 instead
```

Comment: Another 22 bytes alternative: [`java.time.Year::isLeap`](https://tio.run/##hY3LDoIwEEX3fMUsy8IG8QnEP1A2rIxxMdRqiqUltJAYw7fX4mNp2Ewyc8/cU2GPs@pyd0yiMXBAoZ4BgFCWt1dkHPJxBSi1lhwVMOIjUGHmr0Pgh7FoBYMcFOzAVb6OWlFzeuTYpqkwe46Ny0ay6Urpye9Dr8UFaq8jhW2Fup3OgOHHVTyM5TXVnaWNj6xURFFG5sliHb7F/5FttJpCkiiaQOJ4E08hy1/LEAzuBQ).

Comment: And a 20 bytes solution: [`n->n%(n%25<1?16:4)<1`](https://tio.run/##hc2/DoIwEAbwnae4xaQMEIqAIqhPIAujcSgFTbEcBAqJMTw7Fv@MhuWSu@@X@0o2MKvM7xOXrOvgxAQ@DQCBqmivjBeQzCtAVteyYAic6AjQjPR1NPToFFOCQwIIe5jQOuCK4Mr1Y3qkwc4zYzpFs2v6TGr35UMtcqh0GUlVK/B2vgAzP03po1NFZde9shsdKYkEbU5ouA7Md@1/snX8JRI6zgJx3Y27RLzfl9EYpxc)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Nice 20-byter! And didn't realize that the builtin was also 22 bytes. :)

Answer (score 4):

## C#, 23 bytes

```
y=>y%25<1?y%16<1:y%4<1;
```

**[Try it online!](http://ideone.com/d5Xxwb)**

Full source, including test cases:

```
using System;

namespace CountingLeapYears
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<int,bool>s=y=>y%25<1?y%16<1:y%4<1;
            Console.WriteLine(s(1936)); //y
            Console.WriteLine(s(1805)); //n
            Console.WriteLine(s(1900)); //n
            Console.WriteLine(s(2272)); //y
            Console.WriteLine(s(2400)); //y
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## KDB(Q), 27 bytes

```
{0=x mod(4 400)0=x mod 100}
```

## Explanation

```
               0=x mod 100      / boolean of 100 divisibility
        (4 400)                 / 0b -> 4, 1b -> 400
 0=x mod                        / boolean of 4/400 divisibility
{                         }     / lambda
```

## Test

```
q){0=x mod(4 400)0=x mod 100}1936 1805 1900 2272 2400
10011b
```

Answer (score 3):

### PHP - 45 bytes

```
$b=$argv[1]%400;echo !$b|!($b%4)&!!($b%100);
```

Nothing that special really, just abusing type-juggling.

Answer (score 3):

## T-SQL <strike>37</strike> 22 bytes

Saved 15 bytes thanks to BradC's comment.

The usual hardcoded variable for lack of a `stdin`.

e.g.

```
DECLARE @ NVARCHAR(4) = '2016'
```

Then the solution is:

```
PRINT ISDATE(@+'0229')
```

Comment: If I'm reading the challenge right, I think you can save a bunch of bytes by just returning the `1` or `0` directly: `PRINT ISDATE(@+'0229')`

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage), <s>9</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands)

```
т‰0Kθ4Ö
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//YtOjhg0G3ud2mBye9v@/kaGBAQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn2ly/@LTY8aNhh4n9thcnjaf53/hpbGZlyGFgamXIaWBgZcRgYgwhBEGJkbcRmZGBgAAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
т‰         # Divmod the (implicit) input by 100
           #  i.e. 1900 → [19,00]
           #  i.e. 1936 → [19,36]
           #  i.e. 1991 → [19,91]
           #  i.e. 2000 → [20,00]
  0K       # Remove all 0s
           #  i.e. [19,00] → [19]
           #  i.e. [19,36] → [19,36]
           #  i.e. [19,91] → [19,91]
           #  i.e. [20,00] → [20]
    θ      # Pop and get the last item
           #  i.e. [19] → 19
           #  i.e. [19,36] → 36
           #  i.e. [19,91] → 91
           #  i.e. [20] → 20
     4Ö    # Check if it's divisible by 4 (and output the result implicitly)
           #  i.e. 19 → 0 (falsey)
           #  i.e. 36 → 1 (truthy)
           #  i.e. 91 → 0 (falsey)
           #  i.e. 20 → 1 (truthy)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript ES6, 32, 29, 26

Any of following lines works:

```
f=y=>new Date(y,2,0).getDate()&1
g=y=>!(y&3)^!(y%100)>!(y%400)
h=y=>!(y&3|y%100<1&&y%400)
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 57 bytes

Takes the input from stdin, with or without trailing spaces/newline. Only works on little endian machines (yeah, like everyone is on BE these days). Outputs Y or N.

```c
main(y){scanf("%d",&y);y=y%(y%100?4:400)?78:89;puts(&y);}
```

### Explanation

Ungolfed:

```c
int main(int y) {
   scanf("%d", &y);
   y = y % (y % 100 ? 4 : 400) ? 'N' : 'Y';
   puts(&y);
}
```

First, `scanf` reads the year as an integer in y. Then, y is modulo'ed with 4 or 400 depending on whether the year is divisible by 100. If the remainder is zero, the ASCII code for Y is assigned to y, otherwise it gets the ASCII code for N. The value of y is now `0x000000??`, where `0x??` is the assigned character. Being on a little-endian machine, in memory this is stored as `?? 00 00 00`. This is a NULL-terminated C string, containing only the assigned characters. The address of y is passed to puts and the char is printed (with a trailing newline).

Comment: _"You will output in any way that you like that clearly tells the user if it is or isn't a leap year."_ Can you save a couple bytes by returning 1 or 0 rather than 'Y' or 'N'? (I don't really know C at all, just guessing.)

Comment: @AlexA. Thanks for the edit - now I know how to highlight syntax :) I considered it. The ASCII codes are both two digits, so no gain from that (by the way, I'm using uppercase Y and N to save 2 bytes, since lowercases have 3 digits). They are sequential, so that could be useful. Unfortunately, due to operator precedence, I get the same byte count: `main(y){scanf("%d",&y);y=!(y%(y%100?4:400))+48;puts(&y);}`. I can go down to 48 bytes if I can output an empty line for leap years and any character (ASCII 1-99) otherwise, but I feel like it's a bit bending the rules. What do you think?

Comment: I must have done something wrong when counting chars. It's 57, not 59 :)

Comment: Yeah, I'd say that's bending the rules, but you could comment on the question and ask the OP for confirmation. A good tool for counting bytes is [this](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter)--I think a lot of the folks here use it.

Comment: Nah, I'll leave it as it is :)

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>43</s> <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```haskell
l x=mod x(if mod x 25<1then 16else 4)<1
```

If x is divisible by 25, check if it is also divisible by 16, making it divisible by the least common multiple of 25 and 16, which is 400.
If x is not divisible by 25, check if it is divisible by 4.

*Inspired by @David Hammen's answer in [JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50914/41180).*

Comment: I don't know Haskell, but can `==0` be `<1`?

Comment: You are right, it can.

Comment: You can drop the spaces before `then` and `else`.

Comment: The conditional can be equivalently expressed as `(4+sum[12|mod x 25<1])` for a total of 33 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LctBDoIwEIXh/ZziLSG2pjOCSgLewBMQFk2USKSViCYY9ew1RXb/y3xzseP13PchtJgqdzthSrLV@HQ1y2eekLzkJi05ONt5VHB2OCIZ7p1/YI02Rc3FZqt4b3LFhTFKZCdKMmMaoremeIU@AC@KZk5PUS4Z/QLi1z9B@ht@ "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>34</s> 30 bytes

```
echo+!($argn%($argn%25?4:16));
```

I'm using the `+` sign to convert `false` (which would normally be converted to an empty string) to `0`, because that seems to comply closer to the "clearness" requirement (maybe not?). With standard truthy/falsy rules, 1 byte can be saved.

Note: I shamelessly implemented the divisibility by 25 trick from @David Hammen. Without his algorithm it would be 37 bytes:

```
<?=+!(($b=$argv[1])%400^$b%100^$b%4);
```

Run like this:

```
echo 1900 | php -nR 'echo+!($argn%($argn%25?4:16));';echo
```

## Tweaks

- Saved 4 bytes by using `$argn`

Comment: Save one more byte on standard truthy/falsy with `<1` instead of `!()`

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 31 bytes

I am excited to say that I golfed this shorter than the builtin!

```
param($a)!($a%(4,16)[!($a%25)])
```

Outputs true for leap years and false otherwise.

Builtin:

```
[datetime]::IsLeapYear($args[0])
```

Though, if I wanted to stretch the statement 'clearly tells the user if it is or isn't a leap year' and do something non-standard, I could save 3 bytes and use:

```
param($a)$a%(4,16)[!($a%25)]
```

This outputs `0` for leap years and 1 or higher for non-leap years, which I don't like since I'd prefer to return a more standard truthy value for leap years.

Answer (score 2):

### LOLCODE, <s>228</s> <s>202</s> 159 bytes

```
HOW IZ I f YR a
MOD OF a AN 100
O RLY?
YA RLY
MOD OF a AN 4
O RLY?
YA RLY
b R 1
OIC
NO WAI
MOD OF a AN 400
O RLY?
YA RLY
b R 0
NO WAI
b R 1
OIC
OIC
IF U SAY SO
```

Ungolfed:

```
HAI 1.3 BTW "HAI" does nothing functionally in current versions and does not throw an error if you omit it.
HOW IZ I leap YR input
    I HAS A output
    DIFFRINT MOD OF input AN 100 AN 0 BTW Thanks @LeakyNun, In LOLCODE any non-empty values, i.e. 0, "", etc. default to WIN.
    O RLY?
        YA RLY
            BOTH SAEM MOD OF a AN 4 AN 0
            O RLY?
                YA RLY
                    output R WIN BTW "WIN" is true, but in the actual program I used 1 as a truthy value because it's shorter.
            OIC
        NO WAI
            DIFFRINT MOD OF a AN 400 AN 0
            O RLY?
                YA RLY
                    output R FAIL BTW "Fail" is false, but in the actual program I used 0 as a falsy value.
                NO WAI
                    output R WIN
            OIC
    OIC
    FOUND YR output BTW This statement is implied in the golfed version.
IF U SAY SO BTW "KTHXBYE", just like "HAI" has no functional purpose and throws no error on omission.
KTHXBYE
```

In Python ungolfed, because LOLCODE is confusing:

```
def leap:
    if(year % 100 != 0):
        if(year % 4 == 0):
            output = true
    else:
        if(year % 400 != 0):
            output = false
        else:
            output = true
    return(output)
```

Comment: Would it be shorter to define a function?

Comment: probably, but I will edit it later.

Comment: You have updated the main code to be a function, but not the ungolfed code?

Comment: I thought LOLCODE has automatic type coercion, meaning that any non-zero value is equivalent to `WIN`..

Comment: It is, but how could I use that? I don't think I am doing any casting.

Comment: Instead of comparing `year%400` with `0`, you can use it directly

Comment: Fixed bytecount that I don't know how was wrong

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 15 bytes

```
LeapYearQ@*List
```

Mathematica has a built-in for everything. `List` is there to make the integer input into a compact `DateList` object. Returns `True` or `False`.

Comment: `LeapYearQ@{#}&` for 14

Comment: [Just `LeapYearQ` works](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/cc0ab741-c2e5-4edc-b925-ccd4f183d2ba)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 28 bytes

Why calculate when there´s a builtin?

```php
<?=checkdate(2,29,$argv[1]);
```

prints `1` for leap year, empty string for no leap year.
Add `+` after `<?=` for `1`/`0`.

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 40 bytes

```
INPUT Y?0DTREAD STR$(Y)+"/02/29"OUT,,,?1
```

Prints `0` `1` if it's a leap year, otherwise prints `0` and errors.

`DTREAD` parses a date string in the form of `YYYY/MM/DD` and gives the year, month, and day. It can also return the day of the week, and trying to get the day of the week of a day that doesn't exist (Feb. 29 of a non-leap year) will cause an error.

This is shorter than the obvious answer using mod, because SB uses `MOD` instead of `%`, which takes up 3-5 characters.

Answer (score 2):

## x86 machine code, 16 bytes

```
00000000: fcad fdad 2d30 3074 fa86 c4d5 0aa8 03c3    ...-00t.........
```

**Listing**

```
FC         CLD             ; set direction for LODSW to increment
AD         LODSW           ; SI += 2 to start with last two digits
FD         STD             ; set direction for LODSW to decrement
       LD:
AD         LODSW           ; load two ASCII digit chars into AX
2D 3030    SUB  AX, '00'   ; convert to decimal, test if year ends in 00?
74 FA      JZ   LD         ; if so, look at the first two digits instead
86 C4      XCHG AL, AH     ; endian convert
D5 0A      AAD             ; base convert from 10 to word
A8 03      TEST AL, 3      ; mod 4 = 0?
C3         RET             ; return to caller
```

Input string in `SI`, output is `ZF` if is a leap year.

**Explanation**

If the year does not end in `00`, it is a leap year if last two digits `mod 4` is `0`.  If it does end in `00`, it will be a leap year if the first two digits `mod 4` is `0`. Example:

Leap year:

- 19**36**: `36 mod 4 == 0`
- **24**00: `24 mod 4 == 0`

NOT leap year:

- 18**05**: `05 mod 4 == 1`
- **19**00: `19 mod 4 == 3`

**Test Program Output**

[image: LEAP.COM test output]

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, <s>30</s> 25 bytes

Because of an [intentional bug in Excel to maintain compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year_problem#Occurrences)  the year 1900 is treated as a leap year. We can however shift the year by 400 before doing the calculation. The leap year bug then occurs in 1500, which we don't care about anyway. For the following formula A1 serves as input.

```
=DAY(DATE(A1+400,2,29))>1
```

Comment: If you can accept `1` for leap year and and `#VALUE!`  for other years, you can get this down to 19 bytes:  `=("2/29/"&E1+400)^0`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 26 bytes

```python
lambda n:n%4**-~(n%25<1)<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7di/q8IwEAfw3b/iHIqJREhi/VXsKrg4ufkcoqYaqJcSa0EH//VafQ8eIjg63XJH8iFLOAL5Fpfy4LFfZ@lPnZvjZmcAE4zibrd3YxjpwVTxqaozHwDBIahJfyhAjeWgqRMpBWg90k2NpUygCA5LhgIyhpy3fpe8VZnc7UzpPEIKq5nJT1bAa1uG89seEdG36VOjmyIiIiKiZ5SIZpSIiGaUiMiu//76nTlufQh2WyYQnToRWyE8swNRPdKDqytYMLi3TI2lEjqWigv4jwc4uOyZHbTTag3NuYVHy3l9Bw)

Using Kevin Cruijssen's Java approach.

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 28 bytes

```python
lambda n:(n%100or n/100)%4<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7dixasMwEAbg3U9xHUwkEOTkuG1i4jXQJVM2x4OayInAORnFMaQv7zhOoJRCx0633CF9aBGHQH9zbY@eZn2Vb/vanD73BigTFGtEH4CmQ5dxutR9dV@CI9CL2ZsCPcfXoS4QFSTJezLUFDGDJjhqBSmoBEkZPZYy6kzt9qZ1niCHYmXqs1Xws23C5dceE9N/01@Nb4qJiYmJn1EmnlEmJp5RJiZbPv/6kw/a@RDsrs0gPk9iURCM2YHq7unBl2tEMHSwQs9RqyRFLRV8xwMSXDVmBy95V8Jwbu3JStnfAA)

Using Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E approach.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 28 bytes

The lambda takes an Integer `y` representing the year and returns true or false.

```ruby
->y{y%4<1&&y%100>0||y%400<1}
```

Use like this:

```ruby
f=->y{y%4<1&&y%100>0||y%400<1}
f[2004]
# => true
```

or this:

```ruby
f=->y{y%4<1&&y%100>0||y%400<1}
[1936,1805,1900,2272,2400].map(&f)
# => [true, false, false, true, true]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166yulLVxMZQTa1S1dDAwM6gpgbINzCwMaz9X1BaUqwQbWhpbKajYGhhYAokLQ0MdBSMjMyNgCRQVaxebmKBhlqa5n8A)

### Explanation

- `y%4<1&&y%100>0`

  - Years that are divisible by 4 but not by 100 are leap years, e.g. 2004
  - Years that are divisible by 4 and also by 100 are not leap years, e.g. 1700
- `y%400<1`

  - Years that are divisible by 400 are leap years, e.g. 1600

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer! According to site rules, you'll need to use a full program or function instead of assuming the input is in `y`.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Unfortunately, this isn't quite valid as submissions here must be full programs or functions. If you made this a function taking `y` as an argument, that'd be fine.Also, it helps to provide a [TIO](https://tio.run/#ruby) link or similar so others can test your code themselves.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms thanks for pointing out, provided function (with additional 9 characters).

Comment: I just realized there's a 22 bytes Ruby solution already 

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io/), 5 bytes

```
leap?
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?oHfUvU)

Answer (score 1):

## SpecBAS - 77

Not the shortest (but not the longest either).

```
1 INPUT y: PRINT y;"->";"ny"((y MOD 4=0 AND (y MOD 100<>0) OR y MOD 400=0)+1)
```

Uses the standard formula, then prints "n" or "y" based on return value (the final +1 at the end is due to strings being 1-based).

Comment: I don't know the language, but based the fact that there are no booleans, you may be able to save some characters by using something like `y MOD (4+12*(y MOD 100=0))=0`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```
import calendar as y
def a(b):print(y.isleap(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 26 bytes

```
y=>DateTime.IsLeapYear(y);
```

C# lambda (`Predicate`) where the input is a `int` and the output is a `bool`. I use a builtin.

Comment: You don't really need the lambda here, and I would argue the answer is more valid without it.

Comment: @VisualMelon In the meta section, they ask for a function. (If I remember)

Comment: Aye, but DateTime.IsLeapYear is a function ;) generally the rule is that it has to _evaluate_ to a function if it isn't named, and strictly your current submission is meaningless (join the argument [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11224/26981)!), while `System.DateTime.IsLeapYear` is fully typed (`System.Func<int,bool>A=System.DateTime.IsLeapYear` compiles fine) without demanding any user inference (or indeed the text in your answer which specifies the input and output types).

Answer (score 1):

### BASH, 68 bytes

```
((!(y % 4) && ( y % 100 || !(y % 400)))) &&  echo "leap" || echo "no"
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 24 bytes

```
[^04]00$

.+
$*
....

^$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#FcTLCYAwEATQ@9SxgiiE2Un8pAKLEIP9N7G67/Cm@XrjHmwPaUBZYQvKDxgW4b3u8JMbpEPwTkLMPFNWs0Z@)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 45 bytes

```
<?=date_create($argv[1].'-1-1')->format('L');
```

Not the shortest, but using built in functions. Totally not code-golf.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ȷ2*ḍ¥×4ḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///EdiOthzt6Dy09PN0ESP9/1Lj30BKjIhC17NHGdUf3HG5/1LRGxf0/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 14 bytes

```bash
date -d$1/2/29
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PyWxJFVBN0XFUN9I38jy////hpYGJgA)

Outputs via exit code, `0` for leap year and `1` otherwise.

`date -d STRING` will display the date indicated by `STRING`. `$1/2/29` represents February 29th of `$1`, the argument. If `STRING` is not valid, i.e. Feb 29 does not exist, then `date` errors out.

Answer (score 1):

### C++, <s>50</s> 43 bytes

-7 bytes thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
int l(int y){return!(y%4)&&y%100+!(y%400);}
```

And the test code is :

```cpp
auto t = {
    1936,1805,1900,2272,2400
};

for (auto&a : t) {
    std::cout << "Year : " << a << " is " << (l(a) ? "" : "NOT") << " a leap year\n";
}
```

Comment: You can make it `int l(int y){return(y%4==0&&y%100)+(y%400==0);}` to save a few bytes

Comment: I think making `+(y%400==0)` `+!(y%400)` might work as well.

Comment: `int l(int y){return!(y%4)&&y%100+!(y%400);}`

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 22 bytes

```ruby
->n{1>n%(n%25<1?16:4)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6v2tAuT1UjT9XI1MbQ3tDMykSz9n@0oaWxmY6CoYWBKZC0NDDQUTAyMjcCkiYGBrF6uYkF1TUVNQUK0RU6adEVsbG1/wE)

The challenge is quite old, but I noticed there was no valid Ruby answer yet. Nothing particularly original, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## [D](https://dlang.org/), <s>43</s> 42 bytes

```d
T l(T)(T y){return!(y%4)&&y%100+!(y%400);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxNCoMwFITX9RSvASWhoUT7q1J6g3bjplgXoUYa0CgxbRHx7PbhwMDMMHzlPGdQ04zRDAY2WuU@1qzp4O9ZEAx@KMRmaUKwdJq/rS6hkdpQBqO30k3XWge9K7do3aY4GZcX4OACeRjvjjw8iwMPYyF4FJ0iHiGowFvVWiVfb2pVBTIFt@AA9bPaqdpQ8lDSQgKES05A9xhqKtmVkITc7hnBUUKtZAcDHp@GMKRO3jT/AQ)

Another port of @HatsuPointerKun's C++ answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 30 bytes

```
{it%4<1&&(it%100>0||it%400>0)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BC8IwDIXv@xVh4EgOSiviYbgJ3oT9iYIVgjUdtQqy7bfX1r3Tx0teXh4@Opb0MQ74NVgztoBXiQTbHi7eO2sEujRx3BxOumkwg1aqV/NcrEK0pPtb4GlYkGCqIKuc@1oToAMM1twGFpuH5xZqVdN/pWgXfe7C1RgDZ16fwBImqpa0V/r4Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 46 bytes

```
(=(mod(setq x(read))(if(>(mod x 25)0)4 16))0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74r1FQlJlX8l/DViM3P0WjOLWkUKFCoyg1MUVTUyMzTcMOJKxQoWBkqmmgaaJgaKYJpDn/a/43MjAwAAA)

Based on the David Hammen’s method.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clam](https://github.com/dylanrenwick/Clam), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```
=a*rp|e%a*"400"0&%a*"100"e%a*40
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JzP3/3zZRq6igJlU1UUvJxMBAyUANxDIEskBCJgb//xsZGJr91y0DAA)

*-2 bytes thanks to ASCII-only*

Outputs `true` for leap years. Outputs `false` for other years

### Explanation

```
=a*rp|e%a*"400"0&%a*"100"e%a*40
=a*r                             read input and store in a*
    p                            Print..
       %a*"400"                    a* % 400
      e                            ==
               0                   0
     |                             OR
                 %a*"100"            a* % 100
                &                    AND
                          %a*4       a* % 4
                         e           ==
                              0      0
```

Very awkward explanation, but basically what it does is this:

```
print(year % 400 == 0 || (year % 100 && year % 4 == 0))
```

Clam follows JS rules for truthy and falsey values, meaning `year % 100` is true if it does *not* equal 0 (and it's shorter than adding an `e` before it and an `0` after it)

Resulting JS:

```
myVar = read();
console.log(year % 400 == 0 || (year % 100 && year % 4 == 0));
```

Comment: ew 8552. use something nicer like 4545 pls

Comment: jk, [31](https://tio.run/##S85JzP3/3zZRq6igJlU1UUvJxMBAyUANxDQxAPENgfz//40MDAz@AwA)

Comment: also pls fix your indentation in the explanation :|

Comment: [fixed that `year % 100` thing](https://tio.run/##S85JzP3/3zZRq6igJlU1UUvJxMBAyUANxDIEskBCJgb//xsZGJr9BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 9 bytes

```
4♀`*]÷~≤*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7r6Bd@N/k0cyGBK3Yw9vrHnUu0fr/39DS2IzL0MLAlMvQ0sCAy8jI3IjLyATIgnANwWIgwhgkZgZiGYAIkBIjCwMDAA)

### Explanation

```
4         Push 4
 ♀        Push 100
  `*      Duplicate top two elements of stack and multiply (400)
    ]     Wrap stack in array ([4, 100, 400])
     ÷    Check input for divisibility with all array items
      ~   Dump array onto stack
       ≤  Check if divisibility by 100 is <= than divisibility with 400
        * Multiply with the divisibility bool for 4, works like logical and
```

The trick is that `≤` ensures that if a number is divisible by 100, it must also be divisible by 400, but if it's not divisible by 100, anything goes.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt `-!`, <s>8</s> 5 bytes

Locale dependent; in my locale the timezone offset is `GMT+0000` for leap years and `GMT-0025` for all others.

```
ÐUT k
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LSE&code=0FVUIGs&input=MTkzNg) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=0FVUIGs&footer=IVU&input=WwoxOTM2IC0%2bICB5CjE4MDUgLT4gIG4KMTkwMCAtPiAgbgoyMjcyIC0%2bICB5CjI0MDAgLT4gIHkKXS1tUg)

```
ÐUT k     :Implicit input of integer U
Ð         :Create Date object from (defaulting to the first day of the month)
 U        :  The year U
  T       :  The month 0 (months are 0-indexed in JS)
    k     :Get timezone offset as an absolute integer (0 or 25)
          :Implicit output of logical NOT of result
```

And here's my original 8-byte solution, which isn't locale dependent and outputs `1` or `0` for `true` & `false`:

```
ÐUT#< Îu
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=0FVUIzwgznU&input=WwoxOTM2IC0%2bICB5CjE4MDUgLT4gIG4KMTkwMCAtPiAgbgoyMjcyIC0%2bICB5CjI0MDAgLT4gIHkKXS1tUg) (includes all test cases)

```
ÐUT#< Îu     :Implicit input of integer U
ÐUT          :As above but ...
   #<        :  With the date set to 60 (dates wrap over to the next month in JS, so this will give us either 29/02 or 01/03)
      Î      :Get 0-based index of month (1 or 2)
       u     :Modulo 2
```

Comment: You can do [ÐUT91 Îv](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=0FVUOTEgznY=&input=WwoxOTM2IC0+ICB5CjE4MDUgLT4gIG4KMTkwMCAtPiAgbgoyMjcyIC0+ICB5CjI0MDAgLT4gIHkgCl0gCgotbVI=) to output `1` for leap year and `0` for non-leap year.

Comment: @Oliver, yeah, I suppose it would be clearer if I reversed the output. Updated. I came up with a few other similar alternatives, all relying on `new Date` rolling over.

Comment: @Oliver, found a shorter way.

Comment: Every test case is returning `false` for me.

Comment: @Oliver, it's locale dependent.

Comment: Why would a leap year be locale dependent?

Comment: @Oliver, its the timezone offset that's the key; in my locale it's `GMT+0000` for leap years and `GMT-0025` for other years.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-h!`, 8 bytes

Input is taken as a string.

```
k0 ò o%4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/P9tA4fAmhXxVk///lQwtjc2UuLh0MxQB)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 35 bytes

```hs
l x|x!25<1=x!16<1
l x=x!4<1
(!)=mod
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0ehoqZC0cjUxtC2QtHQzMaQCygCZJoAWRqKmra5@Sn/cxMz8xRsFQqKMvNKFDRyFIwMDAw0/wMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>35</s> 34 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to 640KB*

```php
<?=date(L,strtotime($argv[1].-1));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42JbEkVcNHp7ikqCS/JDM3VUMlsSi9LNowVk/XUFPT@v///0YGBhYA)

Came across the `L` option in the PHP date formatter, which returns if the year of the date is a leap year. After that, it was just a matter of trying to get the timestamp of the year in the shortest way (though I'm not too confident this *is* the shortest)

Comment: Well, `strtotime($argv[1].-1)` is 1 byte shorter at least https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42JbEkVcNHp7ikqCS/JDM3VUMlsSi9LNowVk/XUFPT@v///0ZG5kYA

Answer (score 1):

### [Reg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 14 bytes

```
1¿:%[4|]%[;]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///f8NB@K0nVaJMagVjVaOtYoICFgSkA)

[How it works](https://tio.run/##y05N///fkFMBCKKtYzmVFfxS0xNLMvPz9BSCS5NKihKTSxQMFTLTFEqKSlP1uBQO7bfiBKpyKS3IyUxOLElVyMwrSU1PLQLSBaUlXEBjJFUVEEDZLTMvRaEoNTcRSANVlWeWZCgYmXKBJaNNEOo8ITboKBSUFmcomOhxQSVqBGKhKvxLMlKLyjOLYWoMzeCKgEAVyTqgQnQrQUJgF@oBfWthYAoA) (because it contains unprintable characters)

Comment: Maybe leave a note as to why you've spelt it Reg when the link goes to Keg, so people like me don't think you've just made a typo.

Comment: Okay. We have decided to rename "Unofficial Keg" as "Reg."

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/a-ee/w) `d`, <del>10</del> 8 bytes

```
Ö♦Ç⌂╬`§Γ
```

### Explanation:

Uncompressed:

```
25m4&16|m!
```

```
25m        % If the input is modulo-able by 25:
   4&      % Return 4
     16|   % Otherwise, return 16
        m! % Modulo input by the value. Negate the value.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), <s><sup>48</sup></s> 39 bytes

```forth
: f 'd /mod over if d>s then 4 mod 0= ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKainKOjn5qco5JelFilkpimk2BUrlGSk5imYKICEDWwVrP8bWhqbAZXqKSQXcRlaGJjC2ZYGBjC2kZG5EZxtAhf/DwA)

Same as Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

-9 bytes from Bubbler.

Comment: `100 -> 'd`, `drop -> d>s`, and some logic rearrangement gives [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKainKOjn5qco5JelFilkpimk2BUrlGSk5imYKICEDWwVrP8bWhqbAZXqKSQXcRlaGJjC2ZYGBjC2kZG5EZxtAhf/DwA).

Comment: added it to the answer..

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>13</s> 10 bytes

<sup>-3 bytes Thanks to Kevin Cruijssen</sup>

```
25Ḋ[16|4]Ḋ
```

Outputs 1 for truthy, 0 for falsy

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIyNeG4ilsxNnw0XeG4iiIsIiIsIjE5MDAiXQ==)

### Explanation

```
25Ḋ           - is it divisible by 25?
   [16   Ḋ    - if so: check if its divisible by 16
      |4]Ḋ    - if not: check if its divisible by 4
```

---

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

A port of Kevin Cruijssen's answer

```
₁ḋ0ot4Ḋ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigoHhuIswb3Q04biKIiwiIiwiMjQwMCJd)

### Explanation

```
₁ḋ       - divmod the input by 100
  0o     - remove all instances of 0 from the result
    t4Ḋ  - grab the tail of the divmod result and check if it's divisible by 4
```

Comment: Vyxal has a divisible builtin `Ḋ`. :) Also, a port of [my 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177019/52210) is [7 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigoHhuIswb3Q04biKIiwiIiwiMjQwMCJd).

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 125 bytes

```
y=int(input(""))
if y%100==0 and y!=2400:
    print("n")
else:
    if y%4==0:
        print("y")
    else:
        print("n")
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9I2M69EIzOvoLREQ0lJU5MrM02hUtXQwMDW1kAhMS9FoVLR1sjEwMCKSwEICopAqpXylDS5UnOKUyGCYB0mQPUQLpK6SqA6EBehFtWQ//@NjMyNAA)

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal, 100 B

This is a complete `program` according to and requiring a processor complying to ISO standard 7185 “Pascal” (level 0 sufficient).
It demonstrates the importance of sets in Pascal.
Note, `+` and `−` are left-associative thus the following is guaranteed to yield the expected result.

```pascal
program p(input,output);var y:integer;begin read(y);write(0 in[y mod 4]-[y mod 100]+[y mod 400])end.
```

For the standard non-golfed version using `Boolean` operators `and`/`or` see [RosettaCode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Leap_year#Pascal).

### Delphi/Free Pascal, 62 B

The `.toInt64` “type helper” requires at least [FPC](https://www.FreePascal.org/) version 3.0.0.
In FPC, `{$mode Delphi}` or `{$mode objFPC}` have to be selected so `paramStr` returns “long strings”.
Evidently, input is specified as the first argument on the command line.

```pascal
{$mode Delphi}
uses sysUtils;begin write(isLeapYear(paramStr(1).toInt64))end.
```

This is pretty much the same as the [RosettaCode implementation](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Leap_year#Delphi).

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$11\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 9.054 bytes

```
?%25x%4x%16
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyI/JTI1eCU0eCUxNiIsIjE5MDQiXQ==)

Port of Vyxal. Outputs 0 for truthy, positive numbers for falsey.

```
?%25x%4x%16
?%25x       # If mod 25 is > 0
     %4x    # Print mod 4
        %16 # Else print mod 16
```

Comment: -3 chars: `%^4}!%25`

Comment: how does that work exactly?

Comment: `n % 4^!(n%25)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 47 bytes

```go
func(y int)bool{return y%4<1&&y%100>0||y%400<1}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY9NCsIwEEb3OcWgKC1EnaT-o57BvYhEMVJskxJTIdTuvIWbIngob2Oibt7MMHyPmcfzpJt3uxCHszgdIRepImleaGOh35K5bRFyFQYkLF-llb3peyBLdYgcpMrGe62zyhxtaRS4znDBul3XYYgrvN38jLhg9T92D7GvPoqhIu4C8yVstt5SsRki5SyAByQebJaMKZviiP62fMIp90IKHPmXoWdjxJpIbWBHXRAaofwTXl7B2nh3piJHQUYujqEm_1ua5lc_)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `t`, 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ɦḋ0o4Ḋ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UolS7IKlpSVpuharTy57uKPbIN_k4Y6uJcVJycVQ8QVLDC2NzSBsAA)

Port of [Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177019/114446).

##### Explanation

```python
ɦḋ0o4Ḋ  # Implicit input
ɦḋ      # Divmod by 100
  0o    # Remove 0s
    4Ḋ  # Divisible by 4?
        # Implicit output
        # of last item
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB + Aerospace Toolbox, 9 bytes

```
@leapyear
```

Anonymous function that determines if the passed year is a leap year, returning 1 for leap and 0 for not.

Ok so MATLAB has a built-in... But there we are.

---

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 13 bytes

```matlab
@is_leap_year
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9oq6en998hszg@JzWxIL4yNbHof6JGtKGFgYGCkSGIMIAQFrGa/wE)

Octave also has a built-in... cost's 4 more bytes than MATLAB though.

Answer (score 0):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 103 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve][S N
S _Duplicate_input][S S S T T   S S T   N
_Push_25][T S T T   _Modulo][N
T   S T N
_If_0_jump_to_Label_TRUE][S S S T   S S N
_Push_4][T  S T T   _Modulo][N
T   S S N
_If_0_jump_to_Label_LEAP][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_PRINT][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_TRUE][S S S T S S S S N
_Push_16][T S T T   _Modulo][N
T   S S N
_If_0_jump_to_Label_LEAP][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_PRINT][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_LEAP][S S S T N
_Push_1][N
S S N
_Create_Label_PRINT][T  N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

#### Explanation in pseudo-code:

```
Integer i = STDIN-input as integer
If i modulo-25 is 0:
  If i modulo-16 is 0:
    Print 1
  Else:
    Print 0
Else-if i modulo-4 is 0:
  Print 1
Else:
  Print 0
```

#### Example runs:

**Input: `1936`**

```
Command     Explanation                Stack            Heap       STDIN    STDOUT   STDERR

SSSN        Push 0                     [0]              {}
SNS         Duplicate top (0)          [0,0]            {}
SNS         Duplicate top (0)          [0,0,0]          {}
TNTT        Read STDIN as integer      [0,0]            {0:1936}   1936
TTT         Retrieve at heap 0         [0,1936]         {0:1936}
SNS         Duplicate top (1936)       [1936,1936]      {0:1936}
SSSTTSSTN   Push 25                    [1936,1936,25]   {0:1936}
TSTT        Modulo                     [1936,11]        {0:1936}
NTSTN       If 0: Jump to Label_TRUE   [1936]           {0:1936}
SSSTSSN     Push 4                     [1936,4]         {0:1936}
TSTT        Modulo                     [0]              {0:1936}
NTSSN       if 0: Jump to Label_LEAP   []               {0:1936}
NSSSN       Create Label_LEAP          []               {0:1936}
SSSTN       Push 1                     [1]              {0:1936}
NSSN        Create Label_PRINT         [1]              {0:1936}
TNST        Print top as integer       []               {0:1936}            1
                                                                                     error
```

Program stops with an error: No exit defined.
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIgYiTixMEQBwFBSANEgDSIAIkBBSA8RW4gFqAGC6BRQpsDCeIxQVUxfn/v6GlsRkA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Input: `2400`**

```
Command     Explanation                Stack            Heap       STDIN    STDOUT   STDERR

SSSN        Push 0                     [0]              {}
SNS         Duplicate top (0)          [0,0]            {}
SNS         Duplicate top (0)          [0,0,0]          {}
TNTT        Read STDIN as integer      [0,0]            {0:2400}   2400
TTT         Retrieve at heap 0         [0,2400]         {0:2400}
SNS         Duplicate top (2400)       [2400,2400]      {0:2400}
SSSTTSSTN   Push 25                    [2400,2400,25]   {0:2400}
TSTT        Modulo                     [2400,0]         {0:2400}
NTSTN       If 0: Jump to Label_TRUE   [2400]           {0:2400}
NSSTN       Create Label_TRUE          [2400]           {0:2400}
SSSTSSSSN   Push 16                    [2400,16]        {0:2400}
TSTT        Modulo                     [0]              {0:2400}
NTSSN       If 0: Jump to Label_LEAP   []               {0:2400}
NSSSN       Create Label_LEAP          []               {0:2400}
SSSTN       Push 1                     [1]              {0:2400}
NSSN        Create Label_PRINT         [1]              {0:2400}
TNST        Print top as integer       []               {0:2400}            1
                                                                                     error
```

Program stops with an error: No exit defined.
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIgYiTixMEQBwFBSANEgDSIAIkBBSA8RW4gFqAGC6BRQpsDCeIxQVUxfn/v5GJgQEA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Input: `1991`**

```
Command     Explanation                Stack            Heap       STDIN    STDOUT   STDERR

SSSN        Push 0                     [0]              {}
SNS         Duplicate top (0)          [0,0]            {}
SNS         Duplicate top (0)          [0,0,0]          {}
TNTT        Read STDIN as integer      [0,0]            {0:1991}   1991
TTT         Retrieve at heap 0         [0,1991]         {0:1991}
SNS         Duplicate top (1991)       [0,1991,1991]    {0:1991}
SSSTTSSTN   Push 25                    [0,1991,1991,25] {0:1991}
TSTT        Modulo                     [0,1991,16]      {0:1991}
NTSTN       If 0: Jump to Label_TRUE   [0,1991]         {0:1991}
SSSTSSN     Push 4                     [0,1991,4]       {0:1991}
TSTT        Modulo                     [0,3]            {0:1991}
NTSSN       if 0: Jump to Label_LEAP   [0]              {0:1991}
NSSN        Create Label_PRINT         [0]              {0:1991}
TNST        Print top as integer       []               {0:1991}            0
                                                                                     error
```

Program stops with an error: No exit defined.
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIgYiTixMEQBwFBSANEgDSIAIkBBSA8RW4gFqAGC6BRQpsDCeIxQVUxfn/v6GlpSEA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

Answer (score 0):

## ActionScript 2.0, 49 bytes

```
function a(b){trace(!(b%4)&&b%100+!(b%400)?1:0);}
function a(b){                                  } - define a function
              trace(                          );  - that outputs
                                          ?       - if
                    !(b%4)                        - the input divides by 4
                          &&                      - and
                            b%100                 - doesn't divide by 100
                                 +                - plus
                                  !(b%400)        - does divide by 400
                                           1:0    - 1, else 0
```

Not a very good explanation, and I might have swapped some stuff, but this still confuses me, so this is the best you're going to get.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 33 bytes

```c
f(i,a){a=!(i%4|!(i%100)&&i%400);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dh9z9NI1MnUbM60VZRI1PVpAZEGhoYaKqpAXlA2rr2f2ZeiUJuYmaehiZXNZdCQRGQn6ahpJoSk6ekk6ZhaGlspqlpjUXCwsAUu4Ql0FxsEkZG5kbYJUwgOmr/AwA)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 19 bytes

```javascript
y=>!(y%25?y%4:y%16)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/S1k5Ro1LVyNS@UtXEqlLV0Ezzf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGoaWxmaYmF5qghYEppqClgQGGoJGRuRGmoAlI5X8A)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift, 82 bytes**

```
func l(y:Int){y%4==0 && (y%100 != 0 || y%400==0) ?print("Y"):print("N")}
l(y:1936)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f8/rTQvWSFHo9LKM69Es7pS1cTW1kBBTU1Bo1LV0MBAQdFWwUChpkYBKGFgAJTSVLAvKMrMK9FQilTStIIy/ZQ0a7lAZhhaGptp/v8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

A leap year `ERE` is not a "language" per se but it should be easily adaptable to any flavor of regex

(I *think* it should work for ***any*** year, including negative years and also waaaaaaay in the future, assuming `proleptic Gregorian calendar`)

```
ereLEAP := /(([2468][048]|[13579][26]|(^|[0+-])[48])(00)?|0000|^[+-]?0*)$/
```

so an `awk` solution using it would be like

---

```
awk 'function leap(_) { 
         return _~"(([2468][048]|[13579][26]|(^|[0+-])" \
                  "[48])(00)?|0000|^[+-]?0*)$" ? "y" : "n" } ($2 = leap($1))^_'
```

---

and it properly captures the special edge cases, including strangely formatted inputs like negative zero :

```
-2400
-2000
-1600
-1200
-800
-400
-0
0
400
800
1200
1600
2000
2400

777778000
777778400
777778800
777779200
777779600
777780000
777780400
777780800
777781200
777781600
777782000
777782400
```

or ultra extreme inputs, like the year

```
9745314011399999080353382387875188310876226857595007526867
9064572129486907664261024656150658820102592253049162314086
6818345916986520309404657798729631265341953127769995647302
9870789655490053648352799593479218378873685597925394874945
746363615468965612827738803104277547081828589991914111200
```