# Year progress bar

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, date

## Create a progress bar indicating year progress

Your code has to output the percentage of the year already passed form 1st of January of the current year.

You have to display a progress bar and the figure.

## Input

You may use builtins to get the current date, if your language doesen't have it you can get date as input but it would be added to your byte count (has to ba a reasonable input format like 2017-05-12)

## Output

**Bar status:** At least 10 different status relating to figure.

**Figure**: can be rounded or float, has to represent `current (or input) day of the year / 365(366) * 100`

> #### Example
>
> Today 2017-05-12
>
> **Output**
>
> ▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░ 36%

**Take into account leap years** informal definition (occurring evey 4 years)
progess of the year for 12-Feb is 12% on leap years.

[Inspiration](https://twitter.com/year_progress)

Comment: Are we free to choose the characters?

Comment: you can use builtin date to get todays date or input date in an "adecuate" form (not unary).

Comment: you can draw the bar in any way you like as long as looks like a bar

Comment: @MarcosM "as long as [it] looks like a bar" is very unclear.

Comment: @MarcosM This needs a tighter specification before it ready for main. Please could you address the issues raised?

Comment: take into account leap years

Comment: It seems that my dubious method of assuming that every month is 30 days long is how your example works... That doesn't sound right to me

Comment: So we are meant to go from something like `XXXX------` to `XXXA------` to ....?

Comment: @JonathanAllan yes, or you can make a longer bar

Comment: "*take into account leap years*" This contradicts the question which states that a year should be considered to be 365 days. If we *are* taking leap years into account, do we need to do so properly? As in a leap year is one that is divisible by 4, unless it's also divisible by 100, unless it's also divisible by 400.

Comment: Yes, is a date question, progess of the year for 12-Feb is 12% on leap years

Comment: @Shaggy, don't know if it is the wright thig to do but you colud answer 2 codes, one for leap and one for non-leap.

Comment: @MarcosM, while the challenge would certainly be easier in most languages without having to handle leap years, that's not what I'm asking. I'm merely looking for the definition of a leap year for the purposes of this challenge. As none of us will be around to check the solutions come the year 2100, I would suggest using the common definition of a leap year being every 4 years, as I have in my answer.

Comment: @Shaggy, all right I will not ask to handle year 1752 special case either..

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. One last question from me: is the option to take today as an input available to all languages or only those without built-in methods to determine the date and should the input be added to the byte count for the answer?

Comment: Last option seems fair.

Comment: Is `<space>` a valid character to use in the "progress bar"?

Comment: yes, if you can give the impression of progressing `[|         ]` vs `[ |       ]`. Don't know way this is still on hold

Comment: Can you have a look at the alternative solution in my answer, which uses <space> as one of the characters and let me know if it's acceptable? Sounds like it would be. Try posting in chat to ask people if they'd be willing to vote to reopen; those of us who reopened it last time cannot do so again.

Comment: What is a languaje? :D

Comment: ok, spanish speaking here...

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 69 Bytes

```php
for($p=date(z)/(364+date(L))*100^0;$i<100;)echo$i++>$p?_:Z;echo"$p%";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgSi0qyi@KL0otyC8qycxL16hzjffzD/F0dtW0/p@WX6ShUmCbkliSqlGlqa9hbGaiDeb4aGpqGRoYxBlYq2TaABnWmqnJGfkqmdradioF9vFWUdYgvpJKgaqS9f//AA)

[date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

parameter `z` The day of the year (starting from 0) 0 through 365

parameter `L` Whether it's a leap year  1 if it is a leap year, 0 otherwise.

PHP+HTML, 49 Bytes Non-Competenting

```
<progress value=<?=date(z)?> max=<?=364+date(L)?>
```

add `></progress>` if you don't want that the browser makes the rest

Output for today in the snippet

```html
<progress value=131 max=364
```

Answer (score 2):

## Fourier, 68 bytes

***Note, this has been invalidated by rule changes since it does not handle leap years***

```
3d~D4d*30+D~s*100/365~p365(s>0{1}{9618asv~s}s{0}{9617a}i^~i)32apo37a
```

[**Try it in FourIDE!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/editor/?code=M2R-RDRkKjMwK0R-cyoxMDAvMzY1fnAzNjUocz4wezF9ezk2MThhc3Z-c31zezB9ezk2MTdhfWlefmkpMzJhcG8zN2E)

Outputs the bar like in the question but with 365 segments instead of 15.

Makes the assumption that every year has 365 days and every month has 30 days.

Output for today, 12th May:

```
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 36%
```

### Explanation

Firstly, it looks at the day part of the date and the month part of the month. To get how many days have come before this month, you multiply the month by 30. You then add the day to number of days.

From that point, the calculations are academic and the only extra bytes are for drawing the bar.

Comment: How on earth did you answer 3 minutes ago when the question was closed 6 minutes ago?

Comment: @LeakyNun If you don't refresh the page while the question is open, you can still answer on closed questions ;)

Comment: I thought this bug has been pointed out before I left (i.e. 9 months ago).

Comment: Maybe it has been on the desktop site, but it still exists on mobile

Comment: "Each day has to display a different bar "

Comment: @Jonathan So... like a 365 character long bar? Seems excessive

Comment: 366, yes or multiple characters.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES8), <s>137</s> <s>135</s> <s>149</s> <s>155</s> <s>137</s> <s>123</s> <s>110</s> <s>108</s> <s>102</s> <s>100</s> <s>98</s> <s>96</s> 92 +7 bytes

Requires `new Date` to be passed as an argument for an additional 7 bytes.

```
n=>"=".repeat(v=(n-new Date(y=n.getFullYear(),0))/864e5/(y%4?3.65:3.66)|0).padEnd(100)+v+"%"
```

If we can't use spaces in the progress bar then 2 bytes will need to be added:

```
n=>"1".repeat(v=(n-new Date(y=n.getFullYear(),0))/864e5/(y%4?3.65:3.66)|0).padEnd(100,0)+v+"%"
```

---

### Try It

```js
o.innerText=(n=>"=".repeat(v=(n-new Date(y=n.getFullYear(),0))/864e5/(y%4?3.65:3.66)|0).padEnd(100)+v+"%")(new Date)
```

```html
<pre id=o>
```

Comment: "Each day has to display a different bar "

Comment: @Shaggy Turns out it was there from the start, just buried in the question... I wish it wasn't there though :P

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 72+7 = 79 bytes

Uses `-rdate` flag. -1 byte from Tutleman.

```
t=Date.today;d=t.yday;e=t.leap??366:365;$><<?=*d+?-*(e-d)+" #{d*100/e}%"
```

Today's output (2017-05-17):

```
=========================================================================================================================================------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 37%
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you check with December 31st of the previous year, but this does not work for leap years. Dec 31st, 2016 is yday 366.

Comment: If you use `Date` instead of `Time`, you can shave off a chunk of bytes using `Date#leap?` to check if it's a leap year, even after accounting for the `-rdate` flag. Also, you may be able to use `String#ljust` to shorten the number of bit where you add the dashes.

Comment: @GB yeah it seems I forgot the `+1` on the year. The other comment meant I could take that check out anyways, though!

Comment: @Tutleman great! -1 byte, although I guess it would've been -3 because of my other mistake with the leap year check. `ljust` is too long, though; I lose 5 bytes using it.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 133 bytes

```
using static System.DateTime;int k=Now.DayOfYear*100/(IsLeapYear(Now.Year)?366:365);()=>$" {k}%".PadLeft(103-k,'-').PadLeft(103,'@');
```

Uses '@' and '-' Symbols

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 134 bytes

Too long built-ins(

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#RYurDsMgFEA9X1FDLpcCK5vGIaoItpKkLEFQGkqy1OzXWU0zex79XUse1tBiSzkOKe@lNk6suRFxxqqtfBiSxVjm1BlDFVpoJN7oaeLMyQXVGs7jIb/sXzzFS@OtyF7T1mAG7keQwNl1So8j0INSoL73Hw)

```
from datetime import*
D=datetime
N=D.now()
Y=D(N.year,1,1)
P=100*(N-Y).days/-~(D(N.year,12,31)-Y).days
print'H'*P+'-'*(100-P)+'%s%%'%P
```

This line evaluates length of the current year to handle leap ones:

```
-~(D(N.year,12,31)-Y).days
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 75 bytes

```
et3<~@[sS+2m<~e|4%!:L28+T31@"\x1F\x1E\x1F\x1E\x1F\x1F\x1E\x1F\x1E\x1F":i~]@<:++e2 365L+/_'#*100'_*.e<S@'%
```

The bar goes up to 100, so it's a straight percentage bar.

The code for detecting leap years has been "borrowed" from [Dennis's answer on another challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50815/53880).

The code contains several unprintable characters. They have been replaced by hex codes like `\x1F` in this answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@59aYmxT5xBdHKxtlGtTl1pjoqpo5WNkoR1ibOigJC8HhGBCySqzLtbBxkpbO9VIwdjM1EdbP15dWcvQwEA9Xksv1SbYQV31//@vefm6yYnJGakA)

or [try it for every day in 2017](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#Vcq9DsIgGIXhO1HENKTQVPjwp/nCgHs33AghHRgc6sKocutInDQneZKTvB6kugQFA/Yrx8VrRWAiTS1//LsBB8R@bDmmiOXpI2bHry4FioTaWqzPTsBqSnodux3OMImbVpZuN21fKN5LsAaFSED0@TSLQ2R7rqRkkY/JOMu6GvLj3dUP)

**Explanation**

```
et                e# Get the date/time.
3<~               e# Get the first three elements ([year month day]) and dump it on the stack.
@                 e# Bring the year to the top.
[                 e# Begin an array:
 sS+2m<~e|4%!     e#  Check if the current year is a leap year, returning 0 or 1.
 :L               e#  Save the result in L.
 28+              e#  Add it to 28.
 T31@             e#  Push 0 and 31, bring (28 or 29) to the top. 
                  e#    The 0 is there because you can't reduce an empty array (later...).
 "..........":i~  e#  Dump the char codes of the unprintable string into the array.
]                 e# Close array. This now contains the length of each month.
@                 e# Bring the month to the top.
<                 e# Slice the array before the month, to get only those that have passed.
:+                e# Sum the days in those months.
+                 e# Add that sum to the day of the month.
e2                e# Multiply the result by 100.
365L+/            e# Divide by 365+L to get the percentage.
_'#*              e# Duplicate it, and repeat '#' that many times.
100'_*            e# Push a string containing 100 underscores.
.e<               e# Superimpose the hashes onto the underscores.
S@'%              e# Push a space, bring the percentage to the top, and push '%'.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 91 bytes

```python
from time import*
t=gmtime()
d=t.tm_yday
n=365+(t.tm_year%4<1)
print'#'*d+'-'*(n-d),d/.01/n
```

Progress bar is 366 characters long on the pseudo-leap years (from the specification) and 365 on others, but uses the actual day count as a numerator (so it will have precision errors on century non-leap years). This could be fixed with `y=t.tm.year;n=[y%4,y%100,y%400].count(0)%2` in place of `n=365+(t.tm_year%4<1)`

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#lY7NCsIwEITP3acIiGyT2NZQ9RCMT9G7FLaVHPJDCEifvlZb8KrHmfmYmZisz9gF6ieN85iCY9m6gVkXQ8oCsnm4t1FyIJPr7O7TgoI37eUsy9UY@rQ/XRWH@CnboSCJFYrSV8QP1NRH1fh5DXGDuuBCSuGp8b8JkkaBHRndvIaCFlFs4JeUiv/w5wU)** (added tomorrow's output for comparison using extra code in the footer)

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 159 bytes

Relevant Quote: [image: Quote]

```
=LEFT(REPT("|",10*(Now()-DATE(YEAR(Now()),1,0))/(365+(MOD(YEAR(Now()),4)=0)))&"::::::::::",10) & 100*(Now()-DATE(YEAR(Now()),1,0))/(365+(MOD(YEAR(Now()),4)=0))
```

Example Output:

```
|||:::::::38.0821917808219
```

Note that the progress bar rounds down because of how `REPT` works.

---

If using multiple cells is acceptable (I would tend to say it's not), an alternative answer is 97 bytes.

A1: `=YEAR(NOW())`
A2: `=10*(NOW()-DATE(A1,1,0))/(365+(MOD(A1,4)=0))`
A3: `=LEFT(REPT("|",A2)&"::::::::::",10)&10*A2`