# Encode the date in Christmas Eve format

Tags: code-golf, string, date

The day this post was published was Christmas Eve. Tomorrow will be Christmas. Yesterday was Christmas Eve Eve. In two days it will be

```
Christmas Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve Eve
```

.

Your job is to take the date the program is run and encode it in Christmas Eve format.

- If your program is run on Christmas, it should output the string "Christmas".
- If your program is not run on Christmas, it should output the string "Christmas", followed by the string " Eve" repeated `n` times, where `n` is the number of days until Christmas.

  - Note that this must be based on the *next* Christmas. For example, if the day is April 26, 2019, you must do your calculation based on December 25, 2019, not any other Christmas.
  - Remember to count leap days.
- Christmas is December 25th of every year.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins! Note though that the goal is not to find the shortest program in any language, but to find the shortest program in every particular language. For example, if you find the shortest C++ program, then it wins this contest for C++, even if someone finds a shorter program in Python.

Comment: Somehow I knew that this was going to be a PPCG challenge the moment I saw the cartoon - +1 from me

Comment: @BlackOwlKai what cartoon?

Comment: A xkcd cartoon that was published today. https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/christmas_eve_eve.png

Comment: @BlackOwlKai LMBO I didn't even see that comic until your comment. I had already planned to post this, and was just waiting for Christmas Eve. Great minds think alike, I guess?

Comment: You should specify that you mean Dec 25 for "Christmas", unless you want submissions that use a local date or calendar.

Comment: @Sparr fixed it

Comment: @tsh a quick search suggests that is true in all time zones. Since dates are complicated as it is, you may assume anything that is always true (i.e. you do not need to worry about hypotheticals).

Comment: So, is the program supposed to encode a given date, or produce output based on the date it's run?

Comment: @Sean oh, it produces output based on the day it runs. I'll fix the post.

Comment: Does case matter? Can we output all uppercase or all lowercase?

Comment: @Shaggy uhm, we'll say case matters, since the post didn't say otherwise. Too late to change it now.

Comment: What about the second holiday? It´s still Christmas on Decmber 26, isn´t it?

Comment: @Titus yes, but it is also Christmas Eve*364.

Comment: Can the date be a parameter?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire uhm, I'll permit it iff the language does not have the ability to get the current date in another way.

Comment: This may be nitpicking, but 25 December is not _Christmas_ (there are, famously, twelve days to the holiday – or more, or fewer, depending on locality), but _Christmas Day_. It would make more sense to output _Christmas Eve(ⁿ)_ for other days and then _Christmas Day_ on 25 December.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet okay, I'll edit the question and flag all the current answers as being outdated. On a serious note, I'll keep that in mind in the future, but it's kinda hard to fix now.

Comment: We can ignore leap seconds, right?

Comment: @ASCII-only I already told someone else not to, so probably not.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/2089/

Answer (score 58):

## SmileBASIC, <s>73</s> <s>71</s> 67 bytes

```
?"Christmas";
@L?" Eve"*(D!=P);
P=D
DTREAD OUT,M,D
IF M/D-.48GOTO@L
```

The program prints "Christmas", then prints " Eve" every time a day passes, until it is December 25th. (12/25 = 0.48)
May take up to a year to run.

Comment: pure genius ...

Comment: This made me Smile...

Comment: Nice! One of my JavaScript solutions takes a similar approach. However, in JavaScript the wait time is just a best effort.
How is SmileBASIC faring in this regard?

Comment: The code runs continuously (until christmas) and detects the start of each day by checking the date to see if it has changed. I had another version (which was the same length) that used delays instead, but I wasn't sure how reliable it would be.

Comment: @12Me21 that would obviously fail due to leap seconds, this version looks much better.

Comment: The system that this runs on doesn't have leap seconds (or even daylight savings time; you have to adjust the clock manually). A bigger issue is that the delay function (`WAIT`) takes a time in *frames* which are close to 1/60 of a second (but really 1/59.834) and probably isn't as accurate as the clock.

Comment: +1 for thinking outside the box and making me laugh.

Comment: Best laugh I've had in days +1!

Answer (score 24):

## Excel formula, 59 bytes

```
="Christmas"&REPT(" Eve",DATE(YEAR(NOW()+6),12,25)-TODAY())
```

Comment: I think `YEAR(TODAY()+6)` always returns the correct year, thus avoiding the condition.

Comment: Shouldn't it be > (instead of >=) ?

Comment: targumon, Yes, that outputs "Christmas" on it's own

Comment: Neil, that works nicely: ="Christmas"&REPT(" Eve",DATE(YEAR(TODAY()+6),12,25)-TODAY())

Comment: I think `YEAR(NOW()+6)` works as well with 2 less bytes.

Comment: Thanks Engineer Toast, good spot.

Comment: I think ="Christmas"&REPT(" Eve",DATE(YEAR(NOW()+6),12,26)-NOW()) is even shorter and I believe it should work.

Comment: (How does Excel formula get a byte count, what do you use?)

Comment: Just counted the bytes used to express the formula in a text editor

Comment: `NOW()` includes the time, so it won't be an integer and I'm not sure `REPT` would allow that.

Comment: @12Me21 REPT allows it, it floors the given number, which is why I changed the 25 to a 26.

Comment: but this does not give "Christmas" on Christmas day. Check `="Christmas"&REPT(" Eve",DATE(YEAR(DATE(2018,12,25)+6),12,26)-DATE(2018,12,25))`

Comment: Isn't this 59 bytes?

Answer (score 12):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>61</s> 47 bytes

<s>say 'Christmas'~' Eve'x(Date.today...^{.month==12&&.day==25})</s>

```
say 'Christmas'~' Eve'x(Date.today...^/12\-25/)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVJB3TmjKLO4JDexWL1OXcG1LFW9QsMlsSRVryQ/JbFST08vTt/QKEbXyFRf8/9/AA)

*-14 bytes (!) thanks to Jo King*

`Date.today ...^ /12\-25/` is the sequence of dates starting today and ending the day before Christmas.  (The regular expression `/12\-25/` is matched against the string representation of the dates.)  The string `" Eve"` is replicated a number of times equal to the length of that sequence, and is output after the string `"Christmas"`.

Comment: Could you do "month>11" to save a byte?

Comment: Would `/12.25/` work?

Comment: @Cowsquack no, because then it might match the year in dates like `12025-12-24`

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that will never happen

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>112 106</s> 72 bytes

Via @digEmAll and @J.Doe

```r
x=Sys.Date()-1;cat('Christmas');while(!grepl('12-25',x<-x+1))cat(' Eve')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1BbsIwEEX3OcXULGyruEqiUlECq7YnYJuNRWywFGxkT8AIcfbUoW02zSznvf@/72dw8fIExoIE3dkdGmcBHQRz7FqJChqjtfLKIhB0jbwGkmlYi1Fmkd8ygO01vHwmfzP@@S3eYTYC8Ao7bwPENBZQyQachkdliu8kMnRb9MbuU@OcrmpLeR83f3HGRVENFv04eBPwKAPl1eVgWsWe9l6dWkaLUpQLOo9rEZ8Lzh82fJ1VKvpZILUVE1dbwrN7ppn83SJlXizFUPdKOK9gEi0GNEneJsi7yBNZ/idlPpL@Gw)

My original answer was prior to the clarification that the code was to take the date on which the code is run as input. It could be modified as above to save many bytes but I won't bother.

```r
function(x,z=as.Date(paste0(strtoi(format(x,"%Y"))+0:1,"-12-25"))-x)cat("Christmas",rep("Eve",z[z>=0][1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcxLCsIwFIXhuasoF4QEE0mChfqoE3URUjsIJcEM@iC5SunmYyjoSDo8nI/fR5udeLSvrkHXd2RkU6nD9qrRkEEHNIIE9Ng7YnvfakwA1negdCMOkgGXiqs8TT7SJr1weXoXsNUBmDcDgdvbAJuq6VyKupI1pdGSbx@UkMVc2KXCMZsDjw7o6p/JF82ei2SKJaPEz8QP)

Explanation: everyone's at church so I have time to do this. Extract the year, coerce to integer. Make vector of that year's Xmas and the next year's Xmas and subtract the input date to get a vector of two differences between the input date and those two Xmases.

Pick the non-negative one and `cat` "Christmas" with that many "Eves".

Comment: You only use `y` once so you can just use it directly for 108 bytes.

Comment: Also would `z[z>=0][1]` work instead of `min`?

Comment: [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY1BboMwEEX3nGLqLGyroQKUVGkpq7YnyJaNFezEErEje2gcIc5OTdqyKbOc9/7/blzB1YkLaAMCVGcOqK0BtOD1uWsFSmi0UtJJg0DQNuJGPUkUvKWzzQLvE4D9zT99xEA1/3kfBljNAJzEzhkPIa55lKIBq@DeGeMHgQztHp02x9i4pq@1oXwM1V@c8XJy6PvJaY9n4SkvryfdSvZwdPLSMpoXabGl68B5fzfh80tGKVThMR/GnwlSm3ThakN4MiSKid8xUmT5Lp0aN4TzEhbRdkKL5HmBvKRZJLv/pMhmMn4D "R – Try It Online"). According to the last comment, the program must output the text based on the day it runs.
Merry christmas BTW ! :D

Comment: Tweaked yours for [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY1BbsIwEEX3OcXULGyruEqiUlECq7YnYJuNRWywFGxkT8AIcfbUoW02zSzn/f@@72dw8fIExoIE3dkdGmcBHQRz7FqJChqjtfLKIhB0jbzSQDINazGmWeS3DGB7DS@fqbAZ//wW7zAbAXiFnbcBYloLqGQDTsPDmeo7iQzdFr2x@2Sc01VtKe/j5q/OuCiqIUU/Dt4EPMpAeXU5mFaxp71Xp5bRohTlgs7jWsTngvNHGr7OKol@FkhtxcTVlvDsnmkmf7dImRdLMeheCecVTKLFgCbJ2wR5F3kiy/@kzEfSfwM "R – Try It Online"), @digEmAll. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 8):

## [Windows PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>67</s> <s>64</s> 63 bytes

```powershell
for(;1225-'{0:Md}'-f(date|% *ys $i)){$i++}'Christmas'+' eve'*$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py2/SMPa0MjIVFe92sDKN6VWXTdNIyWxJLVGVUGrslhBJVNTs1olU1u7Vt05oyizuCQ3sVhdW10htSxVXUsl87@SSiaIXaz0HwA)

Managed to shave off <s>3 bytes</s> 4 bytes (thanks [Cows quack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41805/cows-quack)) by using the `-f`ormat operator instead of `.ToString()`, and then subtracting the date string from the numerical value 1225 instead of doing a comparison with `-ne`. The resulting integer will be interpreted as a boolean for the conditional where `0` (which will happen on Christmas) is interpreted as `False` (don't enter the loop), and any other value is interpreted as `True` (enter the loop).

Since the integer is on the left now, the date string will be converted to the integer and math will be done, as opposed to the previous version where the `1225` integer was converted to string for the comparison.

#### Original Version

---

## [Windows PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 67 bytes

```powershell
for(;(date|% *ys $i|% tost* Md)-ne1225){$i++};'Christmas'+' eve'*$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py2/SMNaIyWxJLVGVUGrslhBJRPIKMkvLtFS8E3R1M1LNTQyMtWsVsnU1q61VnfOKMosLslNLFbXVldILUtV11LJ/P8fAA)

Using a `for` loop as a `while` loop basically, because it's shorter. In the loop condition we check the current date (`date`, a shortened form of `Get-Date`), piped to `ForEach-Object`'s alias `%`, using the form that can invoke a method by wildcarded name; in this case the method is `AddDays()` on the `DateTime` object, and the value we give it is `$i`.

This gets piped to `ForEach-Object` again to invoke the `ToString()` method, with format string `Md` (month, then day, minimal digits since we don't care for what comes next). This string is then tested to see if it's not equal `-ne` to the number `1225`, which will be converted to a string for the comparison, saving me the quotes.

This is why it doesn't matter that the months and days are single digits, it will never be ambiguous because there's no other day of the year that would stringify to `1225`.

The loop continues until the string *is* `1225`. At the beginning of the program, `$i` will be zero so it will be comparing today's date, and the loop will never execute, but for any other day `$i` gets incremented in the loop body, so that we will have a count of how many days until the next Christmas, automatically accounting for leap years and whether or not Christmas passed this year.

After the loop we just output the string `Christmas` concatenated with the result of multiplying the string `eve` times the value of `$i` (which, on Christmas day, will be `0`, resulting in no `eve`s).

Comment: Apparently the `;` after `{$i++}` is redundant? (also wow you took the lead over bash again)

Comment: @Cowsquack nice! how did I not notice that?!

Answer (score 7):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 89 bytes

```cs
Write("Christmas");for(var t=DateTime.Now;$"{t:Md}"!="1225";t=t.AddDays(1))Write(" Eve");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/vCizJFVDyTmjKLO4JDexWEnTOi2/SKMssUihxNYlsSQ1JDM3Vc8vv9xaRam6xMo3pVZJ0VbJ0MjIVMm6xLZEzzElxSWxsljDUFMTapSCa1kq0JT//wE)

-3 bytes thanks to @JeppeStigNielsen!

My strategy is pretty straightforward:

1. Initialize a loop variable `t` to the current date
2. Print `Eve` if `t` is not Christmas
3. Add a day to `t` and repeat

I tried some fancier things, but this way required the fewest bytes.

Comment: ...do you need to assign t to itself in the incrementor?  I don't have the docs in front of me, but if not, you could save two bytes more.

Comment: oh, it's a struct.  Of course it is.  Nevermind.

Comment: You can substitute `t.Month<12|t.Day!=25` with the shorter `$"{t:Md}"!="1225"`. It uses an interpolated string and a custom DateTime formatting string.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>76</s> 63 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program. Assumes `⎕IO←0` (zero-indexing).

```
⎕CY'dfns'
'Christmas',' Eve'⍴⍨4×12 25⍳⍨⍉2↑1↓⍉date(⍳366)+days⎕TS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862gtAXOdI9ZS0vGJ1LnXnjKLM4pLcxGJ1HXUF17JU9Ue9Wx71rjA5PN3QSMHI9FHvZiDvUW@n0aO2iYaP2iYDmSmJJakaQAljMzNN7ZTEymKggSHB/4Fm/1cAgwIA)

`⎕CY'dfns'` **c**o**p**y in [the dfns library](http://dfns.dyalog.com/n_contents.htm)

`⎕TS` current **t**ime **s**tamp as [year,month,day,hour,min,sec,ms]
`days`<sup>[[c]](http://dfns.dyalog.com/c_days.htm)</sup> find the number of days<sup>[[n]](http://dfns.dyalog.com/n_days.htm)</sup> since 1899-12-31 00:00:00.000
`(⍳366)` add the first 366 integers (0…365) to that
`date`<sup>[[c]](http://dfns.dyalog.com/c_date.htm)</sup> find the dates<sup>[[n]](http://dfns.dyalog.com/n_date.htm)</sup> that correspond to those numbers (366×7 table; one column per unit)
`⍉` transpose (7×366 table; one row per unit)
`1↓` drop one row (the years)
`2↑` take the first two rows (months and days)
`12 25⍳⍨` find the index of the first Christmas
`4×` multiply that by four
`' Eve'⍴⍨` use that to reshape the character list
`'Christmas ',` append that to this

<sup>[c]</sup> code of that function
<sup>[n]</sup> notes for that function

Answer (score 6):

### T-SQL, <s>92</s> 88 bytes

```
PRINT'Christmas'+REPLICATE(' Eve',DATEDIFF(D,GETDATE(),STR(YEAR(GETDATE()+6))+'-12-25'))
```

Edit: Saved 4 bytes thanks to @BradC.

Comment: Nice work. Save 2 with `PRINT'Christmas'+...` and 2 more by using `DATEDIFF(D,` instead of `DATEDIFF(DAY,`

Comment: @BradC Nice, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>111</s> 103 bytes

```python
from datetime import*
d=date.today()
print"Christmas"+" Eve"*(date((d+timedelta(6)).year,12,25)-d).days
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCgMhDADv@wrxlOxuhQrtrafShwSSskJdJYaCr7f1OsxM7XaUM47x1pIdk4mlLC7lWtTWhR8TBStMHXCpmk7zz0NTs0zNb969vuJXmBYAbzNm@RjBHTF0Id2vcY83vDCG/6ON8QM)

Update inspired by [Richard Crossley's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178023/73368).

Explanation:

```python
from datetime import*
# get today as a date, so we don't have to worry about rounding errors due to time
d=date.today()
                              # get the year of the Christmas to compare to
                              # if the current date is after this year's Christmas, the 6 day offset will give the next year
                              # otherwise, returns this year
                              (d+timedelta(6)).year
                         # next Christmas minus the current date
                         date(.....................,12,25)-d
# Christmas, plus (number of days until next Christmas) " Eve"s
print"Christmas"+" Eve"*(...................................).days
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 80 bytes

```ruby
require'date'
t=Date.today
puts'Christmas'+' Eve'*(Date.new((t+6).year,12,25)-t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/vyi1sDSzKFU9JbEkVZ2rxNYFSOuV5KckVnIVlJYUqztnFGUWl@QmFqtrqyu4lqWqa2mAleSllmtolGibaepVpiYW6Rga6RiZauqWaP7/DwA)

Thanks to tsh for [his idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/178003/encode-the-date-in-christmas-eve-format/178022#comment429060_178010)

Comment: 77 bytes (i.e., save 3 bytes) by replacing `puts` with `p`: [Try It Online link](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/vyi1sDSzKFU9JbEkVZ2rxNYFSOuV5KckVnIVqDtnFGUWl@QmFqtrqyu4lqWqa2mA5fNSyzU0SrTNNPUqUxOLdAyNdIxMNXVLNP//BwA)

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 61 bytes

```php
Christmas<?for($t=time();date(md,$t+=86400)-1226;)echo" Eve";
```

Run with `-n` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dd5e887fbcab9459a1752689ee2d6950a35e1d1c).

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>135</s> <s>131</s> <s>121</s> <s>92</s> 88 bytes

My first (naïve) solution (**135b**):

```
t=new Date();n=new Date();n.setMonth(11);n.setDate(25);'Christmas'+' Eve'.repeat((n>=t?n-t:(n.setFullYear(n.getFullYear()+1)-t))/864e5)
```

It sets 2 dates: now and Xmas of this year. If the latter hasn't passed yet, it just diffs them, if it has passed, diffs to next year's Xmas. Uses either diffs for the number of repeats.

(Trying to) Think Outside the Box (**131b**):

```
i=0;f=_=>{t=new Date();if(t.getMonth()!=11||t.getDate()!=25){i++;setTimeout(f,864e5)}else{alert('Christmas'+' Eve'.repeat(i))}};f()
```

The challange specifies WHICH output is required when running the program on a given day, but doesn't specify WHEN to return it...

This will just 'sleep' for a day, increment a counter by 1, and repeat till it's Xmas in order to give the output.

Since JavaScript doesn't guarantee the 'sleep' time, the actual result might be off.

It is also ugly for using the `alert` function, which means wer'e actually not dealing with pure JavaScript, but with browser APIs as well (we can use `console.log` at the cost of 6 extra bytes).

A better approach (**121b**):

```
t=new Date();i=0;while(t.getMonth()!=11||t.getDate()!=25){t=new Date(t.valueOf()+864e5);i++};'Christmas'+' Eve'.repeat(i)
```

Starting from today, increment the date by a day until it's Xmas, then use that loop's counter for the number of repeats required.

Improving (including going through a minifier and using 12Me21's trick to shave extra 5b) (**92b**):

```
for(s='Christmas',t=new Date;t.getMonth()/t.getDate()-.44;)t=new Date(t*1+864e5),s+=' Eve';s
```

Final touches (**88b**):

```
for(s='Christmas',t=new Date;t.getMonth()/(d=t.getDate())-.44;t.setDate(d+1))s+=' Eve';s
```

- For all of the above, REPL is assumed.
- See Vadim's submission - much better than mine!

Comment: I think you can use `t.getMonth()/t.getDate-.48` to check if date is not december 25th

Comment: Ooh, that's sneaky! In JavaScript it actually should be .44 because the month is zero-based (but the numerator and denominator are still coprime so the fraction is unique and the idea still holds) Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site! You can use a 4 space indent to make your code blocks look better.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: [98](https://tio.run/##RcoxDsIwDEDRq3SLrbRlCQgpygSMPUQEhgbUJLKtop4@CBbG//SfcY1y5VR1kJpuxEvJL9pauxcGCeY0cxJdopheQ6Z3d45KXscH6VSyzoC7X3wZcBid8/gfwao9HhztsRcbTHdZyfjKKSsItvYB), `print` is needed since this is a program not a function, _unless_ 1. you turn it into a lambda or 2. you state that you're using a REPL

Comment: `t=new Date(+t+864e5)` is 1 byte shorter.

Comment: Assigning Date to a variable saves couple of bytes too: `x=Date;...t=new x` and so on

Comment: @ASCII-only Actually `print` is not JS (it's browser API, so won't work on Node.js for example) but you're right! I meant REPL and otherwise we incur 13bytes of `console.log()`.

Comment: @AndrewSvietlichnyy - Nice!


@PeteTNT - Not quite... I used `Date` only twice, so replacing each one with `x` saves a total of 6bytes. But `x=Date;` costs us 7bytes...


Anyway, I found another shortcut (see my recent edit). Also see solution by Vadim which is better than mine by 12.5%!

Comment: @targumon it's spidermonkey-specific, not browser

Comment: spidermonkey *is* a browser ;-)

Answer (score 4):

## Bash +GNU date, <s>72</s>, <s>73</s>, 67 bytes

```
for((d=7;`date +%-j -d$d\day`-1;d++));{ x+=\ Eve;};echo Christmas$x
```

- one byte saved replacing `!=` with `-`
- another removing extra space
- fix -3 bytes `d=0`, because `date -dday` is date+1 and doesn't work on 25/12
- 6 bytes saved thanks to Toby Speight using %-j format to avoid 0 padding (and octal conversion) and shorter than %d%m compared to 2512

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SEMjxdbcOiElsSRVQVtVN0tBN0UlJSYlsTJB19A6RVtbU9O6WqFC2zZGwbUs1brWOjU5I1/BOaMos7gkN7FYpeL/fwA)

Comment: Hmmm, why does `=~` not work in the for-loop conditional?

Comment: because the for loop  condition is an arithmetic expression, words are coerced to integer also number starting with 0 are assumed in octal, that's why 1 is prepended

Comment: Instead of prepending `1` in two places, we could use `%-d` format (saving 1 byte net).  But we can save more by starting with `d=7`, and then comparing the Julian day with 1st of January: ```((d=7;`date +%-j -d$d\day`-1;d++))``` - [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SEMjxdbcOiElsSRVQVtVN0tBN0UlJSYlsTJB19A6RVtbU9O6WqFC2zZGwbUs1brWOjU5I1/BOaMos7gkN7FYpeL/fwA).

Comment: @TobySpeight interesting ideas, updated

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>68</s> <s>65</s> 61 bytes

*Golfed 4 bytes thanks to [Nahuel Fouilleul](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70745/nahuel-fouilleul)* by using ``` `` ``` command substitution and `eval` in place of sed `e` and `xargs`

```bash
echo Christmas `eval date\ -d{0..366}day\;|sed /c.25/Q\;cEve`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1/BOaMos7gkN7FYISG1LDFHISWxJDVGQTel2kBPz9jMrDYlsTLGuqY4NUVBP1nPyFQ/MMY62bUsNeH/fwA)

Inside the ``` `` ``` [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution), we have

`eval` run the following string as shell commands

- `date\ -d{0..366}day\;` under [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) of `{0..366}`, this results in the string `date -d0day; date -d1day; date -d2day; ... date -d366day;`, each command in this string computing the date between 0 and 366 days from present resulting in output of the format `Wed Dec 26 18:22:33 UTC 2018`, with each in its own line

`|sed` upon which, call the following sed commands

- `/c.25/Q` if the regex `/c.25/` is matched, `Q`uit without printing
- `\;cEve` otherwise change the line to `Eve`

All the required number of `Eve`s are produced each on its own line. This output is captured in ``` `` ```, and is subject to [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#Word-Splitting) where words are split on newlines. Each word is fed as an argument to `echo`.

`echo Christmas ...`

Each argument to `echo` is printed by being separated by spaces, resulting in the desired output.

Comment: There's nothing really `bash`-specific about this solution.  It requires GNU `date`, `sed` and `seq` though.

Comment: [-4 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1/BOaMos7gkN7FYISG1LDFHISWxJDVGQTel2kBPz9jMrDYlsTLGuqY4NUVBP1nPyFQ/MMY62bUsNeH/fwA)

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Thanks, nice trick of using backtick command substitution to avoid xargs and using eval to skip out on seq

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 128 bytes / Python 3, 130 bytes

of course, two less bytes with Python 2

```
from datetime import date as D
T=D.today()
Y=T.year
a=(D(Y,12,25)-T).days
print("Christmas"+" Eve"*[a,(D(Y+1,12,25)-T).days][a<0])
```

Comment: [105 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYzBCsMgEAXv@QrxtJukQlPaW0@lH7Lglgg1ij4Cfr2t12FmcsOejlvvn5Ki8QJFiGpCzKlgnvAcyCF5acRTLuEA2ddeQkWUahdr3qfamYZGhGXUXr8QejC7plLW67Zud76A3X9Sufcf)

Comment: @tsh That's an amazing approach!

Comment: [Python 2 doesn't need a space after print so it's 128 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYuxCsMgFAB3v0KctLHSCN3qVPsHLiFkeBBLHIyij4Jfb9KOHY@7yw23tOve3yVFugJ6DNHTEHMq@GMKlVrijFWYVmhckMk41TwUAoZbPslRS30XVyfU6SvJJezInlsJFSNUNjD6@nh2mUF@82H8G5YZHrel9wM)

Comment: [-2 bytes by implementing `as D` by yourself](https://tio.run/##XYs9CsMgFIB3TyFOmlhphG51ir2BSwgZHsQSB6Poo@DpbbN2/X5ywyOduvd3SZHugB5D9DTEnAoOxJoLEWeswrRD44IsxqnmoRAw3PJFTlrqh7g5oX6@klzCiWw@SqgYobKR0dfHs2EFeeXj9DdsKzzvW@9f)

Answer (score 3):

## VBA (Excel), 108 bytes

Copy in a blank module. Prints to the Immediate window:

```
Sub X:s="Christmas":d=Now:For t=1 To (DateSerial(Year(d+6),12,25)-d):s=s &" Eve":Next:Debug.Print s:End Sub
```

**Note:** Using `:` instead of line breaks saves two bytes per line.

Notice that the VBA editor will insert additional spaces between keywords, operators, etc... and parenthesis after the Sub definition, but if you copy and paste this code it will work (I couldn't get rid of that space before the `&`).

Not bad for VBA (for once).

Comment: *`Christmas` :|

Comment: @ASCII-only: removing the space before the `&` throws an error

Comment: -1 bytes. Thanks to @ASCII-only for catching the typo

Comment: You can cut this down to 71 chars by converting it to an immediate window function and removing the temporary variable for `now`. When you do that, it should look something like `?"Christmas";:For i=1To DateSerial(Year(Now+6),12,25)-Now:?" Eve";:Next`

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3, 106 Bytes

```
from datetime import*
d=date.today()
print("Christmas"+" Eve"*(date((d+timedelta(6)).year,12,25)-d).days)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 66 bytes

```
d=[]as Date
print'Christmas'+' Eve'*(new Date((d+6).year,11,25)-d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P8/xTY6NrFYwSWxJJWroCgzr0TdOaMos7gkN7FYXVtdwbUsVV1LIy@1HKxCQyNF20xTrzI1sUjH0FDHyFRTN0Xz/38A)

Courtesy of @ASCII-only

Comment: You need to print it out since this is a full program not a function

Comment: > `Chistmas` :/

Comment: [fixed, 149](https://tio.run/##LY09C8IwFAD3/IpuTfwItOBUOoh1UxxEQcThYdM2kuaV9Bkp9L/HWlzv4K52iH4IQbcdOope4EGSbpVcsDI/4BNMAaSkxQ8XrHPaEo93jdM9tdDHglXoeFbKWtERLTVXMG/FxTpJx3GmBQynalYTTTdZuczvyYrUbwdGTim0eLGaZLG9nR/iv4j2XsUihC8)

Comment: [123](https://tio.run/##Lc2xCoMwEIDhvU/RLbmhAYVO4lS7Wbq5H03UlJiT5IwIvnsq0vX7h38IRGnLeQ7WsxSPMdjIE0YBl56C1PUXEyq2k1EtfdA1yEZ5WiVUWg2GX@R57NAtRsKtKPf91Aa3d3@mQ8t7pWutZrfEw6MsAP636zMZATn/AA)

Comment: taking your first one and using Groovy 2.5 slims it down to [115](https://gist.github.com/bdkosher/881c637d8a2a8092541b2003f454630b).

Comment: We'll just need to ask Dennis to update Groovy and we'll get [112](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P@/oCgzr0RD3TmjKLO4JDexWF2TKy2/SCPFNiuxLFGvJDM3Vc8nPzkxxyWxJFUvL79cQ9M6RS89tcQ3P68kIywxpzRVQ1PX0KimBizqkljpnwaWAooamVqnaNsaakKtUHAtS1XX/P8fAA) maybe? Hmmmmm

Comment: nevermind, if we use crusty java.util.Date we can get it down to [76](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P8/xTY6NrFYwSWxJJWroCgzr0RD3TmjKLO4JDexWF2TKy2/SMM6RS83P68kQ9fQsKYmRS8FqFTXyNQ6RdvWUBOqRcG1LFVd8/9/AA)

Comment: You mean [73](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P@/oCgzr0RD3TmjKLO4JDexWF2TKy2/SCPFNjo2sVjBJbEk1TpFLzc/ryRD19CwJkUvBSiia2RqnaKtrQnVq@Balqqu@f8/AA)

Comment: What hackery does Groovy use to make that work? Looks like Scala doesn't have a lot of it

Comment: Seems like we're not going to get any lower for a while :P you might want to update your answer (protip: in the topbar of TIO, there's a button which opens a page that generates all kinds of formatted links for you, including one that is formatted for PPCG: esc + s + g. If you want to keep showing your previous score(s) just surround each score with <s> and </s>)

Comment: [69](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P@/oCgzr0TdOaMos7gkN7FYnSstv0gjxTY6NrFYwSWxJNU6RS83P68kQ9fQsCZFLwUoomtkap2ira0J0angWpaq/v8/AA)

Comment: [66](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P8/xTY6NrFYwSWxJJWroCgzr0TdOaMos7gkN7FYXVtdwbUsVV1LIy@1HKxCQyNF20xTrzI1sUjH0FDHyFRTN0Xz/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 157 bytes

I thought that I would be able to avoid including `time.h` but that just gave segment faults.

```c
#include <time.h>
*t,u;f(){time(&u);t=localtime(&u);t[5]+=t[4]>10&t[3]>25;t[4]=11;t[3]=25;u-=mktime(t);printf("Christmas");for(u/=86400;u++;printf(" Eve"));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc5BDoIwEIXhvadoMCGtiIKCMRnLxngKwgILSGMLBqZsCGfH4kJdfn/mJSP8hxDzWjZCmaIklx4LJe@7OvlrKHVpy2qDWwMVZeMSqGsYIFetyNXPaZx5HNMoS8LAxfSYJYcYFvMwhMXc2vhcPz8bZPDqZIMVda51J3vUee8wqNqOmj0/n6IgAON53yNyG0qHMZhma6Jz2dChlQUjI7F/AZnmNw)

Comment: IMO you should leave out the `#include <stdlib.h>`, not like it does anything at all here

Comment: Suggest `*t;f(u)` instead of `*t,u;f()` and `#import<time.h>` instead of `#include <time.h>` and `5[t=localtime(&u)]` instead of `t=localtime(&u);t[5]`

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>116</s> 113 bytes

```scala
var d=new java.util.Date
print("Christmas")
while(!(""+d).contains("c 25")){print(" Eve");d.setDate(d.getDate+1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7LasMwEEX3/gplVhIG5UFbCsGL0qQ7r9IfUKVJM0GSjTRxWoK/3Y1w6aKzmoE7555sjTdT93FGy6IV@MUYXRYvfX@bBpOEayJexdkMRl@YvN4ZxqpPFFnC6ylR5mAyqOp6Io9yIQFqp7TtIhuKWYIVm0dQ6vb7IvYDgto6nZELSjr9OW/1Wo3TWC2XpZWa1XYm/rXzXU0fKPQeS/ytS8HcgW3rHCh9nM/Dd2YM2l5SwsjvFLAl7ynXpBYNrDfF5Z8K1c3z08OqzDj9AA)

Where `c 25` is short for `Dec 25`.

Comment: I think you can use `contains("c 25")` instead of `matches(".*c 25.*")`

Comment: Thanks, three bytes less! 

Comment: wow, nicely done, toString of date was nice

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>86</s> 77 bytes

Using REPL it would be

```
for(c='Christmas',d=new Date;!/c 25/.test(d);d=new Date(+d+864e5))c+=' Eve';c
```

Kudos to ASCII-only for **-9** bytes

Comment: [77](https://tio.run/##RclBCsMgEADAr9iTik0CJQkF8dT0IbJuiS0xsruk9PXm2LnOOx6RgXKVjmtOSNtePvhr7bWTgaAfK2WWLbK@plDwq5Yo6C8DqNs09IIsJln/L@OSu88jTtaCC1o9D9QeWqVcxIBtJw)

Comment: Bravo! You did much better than me. May I offer to shave an extra byte?

`for(c='Christmas',d=new Date;!/c 25/.test(d=new Date(+d+864e5));)c+=' Eve';c`

or this variant:

`for(s='Christmas',t=Date.now();!/c 25/.test(new Date(t+=864e5));)s+=' Eve';s`

both are 76 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <strike>137</strike> 118 bytes.

118 bytes

```
t,d,month,day=os.time,os.date,1,-6year=d"%Y"+(d"%D">"12/25"and 2or 1)print("Christmas",d" Eve":rep(d("%j",t(_G)-t())))
```

137 bytes (previous)

```
t,d=os.time,os.date a=d"*t"a.year,a.month,a.day=a.year+(d"%m%d">"1225"and 1 or 0),12,25 print("Christmas",("Eve "):rep((t(a)-t())/86400))
```

It's worth noting that it doesn't work in LuaJIT (syntax error)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first post!

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 91 bytes

```julia
using Dates
t=today()
print(:Christmas," Eve"^~-(tonext(==((12,26))∘monthday,t)-t).value)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v7Q4My9dwSWxJLWYq8S2JD8lsVJDk6ugKDOvRMPKOaMos7gkN7FYR0nBtSxVKa5OV6MkPy@1okTD1lZDw9BIx8hMU/NRx4zc/LySDKBWnRJN3RJNvbLEnNJUzf//AQ)

- -1 byte thanks to @MarcMush: Substitute `1>0` for `true`
- -5 bytes thanks to @MarcMush: Substitute `_.value` for `Dates.value(_)`
- -1 byte thanks to @amelies: print symbol `:Christmas` rather than string `"Christmas"`
- -1 byte thanks to @MarcMush: compose functions with `∘`
- -7 bytes thanks to @MarcMush: use Boxing Day as the end date and subtract one in order to eliminate the `same=true` parameter

Comment: -1 byte with `1>0` instead of `true`

Comment: And I believe you can access the date field directly, `x.value` maybe instead of `Dates.value(x)`

Comment: use `:Christmas` symbol instead of string, save one byte, i.e, `print(:Christmas," Eve"^(t<etc...>`

Comment: -1 byte: `==((12,25))∘monthday` instead of `x->...`

Comment: remove `same=true`, go to the 26th and subtract one: `" Eve"^~-(tonext(==((12,26))∘monthday,t)-t).value)`

Answer (score 1):

## MySQL, 102 bytes

pretty much the same as [Neil´s T-SQL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178031/55735). There seems to be no shorter way in SQL.

```mysql
select concat("Christmas",repeat(" Eve",datediff(concat(year(now()+interval 6 day),"-12-25"),now())));
```

[Try it online](https://sqltest.net/#403120).

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 123 bytes

Thanks to ASCII-only's work.

```scala
print("Christmas")
var d=new java.util.Date
while(d.getMonth()<11||d.getDate()!=25){print(" Eve");d.setDate(d.getDate()+1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYyxCsIwFAD3fkXMlCAEIjhpB6mO/Yhn8zApNQ3JMxXafntE6eB6d1zqYIAy3nvsiLXgPMM3oTeJXUKYS4jOk@CNjS7RExKXVYbITO1xYj1kUC9yg7oCYTVZN6Aw6oHUjp6skGetl@UHvoGQu/pwlPP2ZLeMXJ6MSpv@C/darmUtHw)

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) + [Joda-Time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time), 140 bytes

```scala
import org.joda.time._
var s="Christmas"
var d=DateTime.now
while(d!=d.withDate(d.year().get(),12,25)){d=d.plusDays(1);s+=" Eve"};println(s)
```

Does not run in TIO since it requires Joda-Time library.

Comment: [no joda, 154](https://tio.run/##NY2xDoIwFEV3vqIytUsTSJyUwYibxM39SZ9SUtqGPkAjfHslJK73nJMbajAQo3u0WBOrGL4JrQrs5P3X99oST89NrwN1EFKRjNAzVbQwgiTdoby6tS@BUFo3cZFMjTbIlXwhVc5ScwczIBfHLJ/nbS3hc3tuiItdke/F/4VdRkzFQRVKejOE1Qs8E8sS4w8). sadly can't get `java.util.Date` to work here :/

Comment: [148](https://tio.run/##TYzBCgIhFADv@xXmSQkEg061h6iO@xGv9ZEu5oq@3KDdbzeKgq4zw@QePNQ6XgbsiXXgAsMHYTCZHWJ8xuQCCX60yWW6QeayKZCYaQNObIAC6k7OqxMQNpN1HoVRV6RuDGSF3Gs9zx/wDoRctZut/D3ZuSCXO6PyV/@Fay2XpdYX)

Comment: Ah @ASCII-only I did not count `object Main extends App{}` chars in my counting (cause I didn't in my other Scala answers either). If we take that out you beat me ^^

Comment: The `withDate()` call is so expensive...

Comment: 1. remember you need to specify language as "Scala + Joda-Time" since you use an external library and 2. not going to use my changes? it's shorter _plus_ doesn't need a library :P

Comment: Ah yeah thanks, but I thought you post it in a separate answer..? maybe I dreamt

Comment: Nah, I haven't posted it yet. I don't really know Scala anyway so I basically just combined your answer and the Groovy answer >_>

Comment: I see :) well I'll add your work today. Thanks!

Comment: you don't have to do this, but i'd put the shorter answer first so those that have the PPCG-Design userscript see it in the leaderboard

Comment: I'll do it nonetheless.

Comment: damn, we were beaten :P

Comment: yeah, they used date as a string... :D

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 91 bytes

```
n=datetime
x=datetime(year(n+6),12,25)
s='Christmas'
while days(x-n)>=1 n=n+1 s=[s,' Eve'] end
```

## MATLAB Non-looper, 100 bytes

```
x=datenum(datetime(floor((now+5)/365.2425),12,25))
d=x-now
['Christmas' repmat(' Eve',1,min(d(d>=0)))]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>93</s> <s>89</s> <s>87</s> 81 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'ŒÎžfže«Ž9Ú.S©DΘžg+т‰0Kθ4ÖUi390že-X+ë®_i0ë•ΘÏF•º11£®ª₂+ā2QX*+13žf-.£Ože-]Fð'»ˆ}J™
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AYMAfP9vc2FiaWX//yfFksOOxb5mxb5lwqvFvTnDmi5TwqlEzpjFvmcr0YLigLAwS864NMOWVWkzOTDFvmUtWCvDq8KuX2kww6vigKLOmMOPRuKAosK6MTHCo8KuwqrigoIrxIEyUVgqKzEzxb5mLS7Co0/FvmUtXUbDsCfCu8uGfUrihKL//w) or [Try it online with an emulated self-specified date of 'today'](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a8UUFqikKiQkliSqpCZp1CSkaqQll@Um1iikJKi6@urWwkECiX5CqXFqQqJxQqJOSWpRXmJJZllqQrFJYlFJZl56RDNGqm5pTlARgqEm5@moF6Sn5JYqa5ppRTDxaVkZKpraKRrZGBooaSue2hh2H/1o5MO90UeWhHkdXSv5eFZesGHVrqcmxF5bof2xaZHDRsMvM/tMDk8LTTT2NIg8sJe3Qjtw6sPrYvPNDi8@lHDonMzDve7AelDuwwNDy0@tO7QqkdNTdpHGo0CI7S0DY0jD7cW6@odWuwP0hnrdniD@qHdp9tqvR61LPr/HwA).

**Old <s>93</s> <s>89</s> 87 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) approach that loops over the days one by one:**

```
žežfžg)V'ŒÎ[Y¨JŽ9ÚQ#Y`т‰0Kθ4ÖUD<i\28X+ë<7%É31α}‹iY¬>0ëY1¾ǝDÅsD12‹i>1ë\1Dǝ¤>2}}ǝVð'»ˆ}J™
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AYMAfP9vc2FiaWX//8W@ZcW@ZsW@ZylWJ8WSw45bWcKoSsW9OcOaUSNZYNGC4oCwMEvOuDTDllVEPGlcMjhYK8OrPDclw4kzMc6xfeKAuWlZwqw@MMOrWTHCvsedRMOFc0QxMuKAuWk@McOrXDFEx53CpD4yfX3HnVbDsCfCu8uGfUrihKL//w) or [Try it online with an emulated self-specified date of 'today'](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a8UUFqikKiQkliSqpCZp1CSkaqQll@Um1iikJKi6@urWwkECiX5CqXFqQqJxQqJOSWpRXmJJZllqQrFJYlFJZl56RDNGqm5pTlARgqEm5@moF6Sn5JYqa5ppRTDxaVkZKpraKRrZGBooaSue2jh/zD1o5MO90VHHlrhdXSv5eFZgcqRCRebHjVsMPA@t8Pk8LRQF5vMGCOLCO3Dq23MVQ93Ghue21j7qGFnZuShNXYGh1dHGh7ad3yuy@HWYhdDI5C4neHh1TGGLsfnHlpiZ1Rbe3xu2OEN6od2n26r9XrUsuj/fwA).

**Explanation:**

05AB1E doesn't have any builtins for dates, except for receiving the current year/month/day/hours/minutes/seconds/microseconds, so most bytes are used for manual calculations.

```python
'ŒÎ           '# Push dictionary string "christmas"
žfže«          # Append the current month and current day together
        .S     # Compare it with
     Ž9Ú       # Compressed integer 1225
               # (1 if >1225; 0 if ==1225; -1 if <1225)
          ©    # Store this comparison in variable `®` (without popping)
D              # Duplicate it
 Θ             # Check if it's equal to 1 (1 if 1; 0 if 0 or -1)
  žf+          # Add the current year to it
     т‰0Kθ4Ö   # Check if this is a leap year:
     т‰        #  Divmod it by 100
       0K      #  Remove the 0s
         θ     #  Only leave the last item
          4Ö   #  Check if it's divisible by 4
            U  # Pop and store this is_leap_year in variable `X`
i              # If the comparison is 1:
 390že-        #  Push 390 minus the current day
               #  (390 is 31 for days in December and 259 for days of Christmas Day)
 X+            #  Add the is_leap_year check from variable `X`
ë®_i           # Else if the comparison is 0:
    0          #  Push 0
ë              # Else (the comparison is -1):
 •ΘÏF•         #  Push compressed integer 5254545
      º        #  Mirror it to 52545455454525
       11£     #  Only leave the first 11: 52545455454
          ®ª   #  Convert it to a list of digits, and append the -1:
               #   [5,2,5,4,5,4,5,5,4,5,4,-1]
            ₂+ #  Add 26 to each: [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,25]
 ā             #  Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping):
               #   [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
  2Q           #  Check which is equal to 2: [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    X*         #  Multiply each by the is_leap_year check of variable `X`
      +        #  Add the values at the same positions in the lists together
 13žf-         #  Push 13 minus the current month
      .£       #  Only leave that many items from the end of the list
        O      #  Sum them together
 že-           #  Subtract the current day
]              # Close the if-else statements
 F             # Loop that many times:
  ð            #  Push a space character " "
  '»ˆ         '#  Push dictionary string "eve"
 }J            # After the loop: join the entire stack together
   ™           # Titlecase each word
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

---

```python
žežfžg)V   # Get the current [day,month,year] and save it in variable `Y`
'ŒÎ       '# Push dictionary string "christmas"
[          # Start an infinite loop:
 Y¨J       #  Remove the year, and join the month and day together
       Q   #  Check if this is equal to
    Ž9Ú    #  Compressed integer 1225
        #  #   If this is truthy (thus it's December 25th): stop the infinite loop
 Y`т‰0Kθ4ÖUD<i\28X+ë<7%É31α}‹iY¬>0ëY1¾ǝDÅsD12‹i>1ë\1Dǝ¤>2}}ǝV
           #  Go to the next day, and set `Y` to it
 ð         #  Push a space " "
 '»ˆ      '#  Push dictionary string "eve"
}J         # After the infinite loop: join the entire stack together
  ™        # Titlecase each word
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177019/52210) to understand the `is_leap_year` check.

[See this 05AB1E answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173126/52210) to understand how we go to the next day (with the second longer approach).

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `'»ˆ` is `"eve"`; `'ŒÎ` is `"christmas"`; `Ž9Ú` is `1225`; and `•ΘÏF•` is `5254545`.

Comment: Clever golfing!

Answer (score 1):

## [q](https://code.kx.com/home), 53 bytes

```
"Christmas",(4*(not 12 25~`mm`dd$.z.d+)(1+)/0)#" Eve"
```

## k, 50 bytes

```
"Christmas",(4*(~12 25~`mm`dd$.z.d+)(1+)/0)#" Eve"
```

Increment counter while the date is not Dec 25th, then take that number of copies of " Eve" and append to "Christmas".

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 178 bytes

```go
import(."time";."strings")
func f()string{n:=Now()
y:=n.Year()
if n.Month()>11&&n.Day()>25{y++}
return"Christmas"+Repeat(" Eve",int(Date(y,12,25,0,0,0,0,UTC).Sub(n).Hours())/24)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZDBSsNAEIbveYphwDJL0zUJVqSyBWkrXizS1oPgZS277aLZlM1GCaUv4Ct4CYIv4M1H8W1Mk1xkDvPzD_x8_3x8brLqZyfXz3KjIJXGBibdZc5z1KnHr8LrwcXvd-sRR29ShZccc--M3eTIAl3YNWhirbO3IzHP3ogF5UhY_qCkq7XRYPltZv2W2DiOez3Lp7KsdTLcl_3-IXDKF87iZOtM7lOZY3-hdkp6Qpi9KgyN9TSVXlEZxkmYDMOom_vVhPFl8USW8ZuscDkxdpqcsUNH_t7gHXsRg32gM5dKDyMBmETR-SCKB1GCwV2N7l8soRAClqurxQpqVZdrDprwJH-0IMZw3BhC05BfN2HUZrLw-AT2Pwpm8yl0UR1RVbX7Dw)

And a variant that takes a `Time` as input, 175 bytes:

```go
import(."time";."strings")
func f(n Time)string{y:=n.Year()
if n.Month()>11&&n.Day()>25{y++}
return"Christmas"+Repeat(" Eve",int(Date(y,12,25,0,0,0,0,UTC).Sub(n).Hours())/24)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVFNSwMxEMVrfkUIWBKaxm3ailS2IG3Fi0Xa9SAqEku2XXSzJZlVlqW_xEsRPHv2p-ivcT96sUiZwwzzmHlv3ry9L5LN10rNn9RC41hFBkXxKrEgSBgD-UghbJ18f9Y9KghEsSangjiwkVk4wlCYmjkOqcFBAbG6n2d934gbrSxlKAqxEZeJgSVlg3a70TBipLKilr08azbXyGpIrSHDpY0cxMqR5lSvtAJK8PhFEx4ZoCMFmma8LbnscW8b18GQiVn6SA0TF0lqHWXsSHbZupb9c9CtxJVXUYZzBNqBw30f396XYnM0SV4p46haLj3Z-Wf_Ltrdi3b2osc76BqFiY0VlJKI9LzjltdueZKgq8JEeDaU-L6PZ8HZNMBFVZqdWPzAqwGrTPGx-qS8nggpOXR3BvsDXGbCMYjzioHWRIwXnwLGCuY_FHg8GeEtxda8zabOvw)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 141 bytes

```cs
var g=DateTime.Now;Write("Christmas"+string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(" Eve",(new DateTime(g.Year+(g.Day>25&g.Month>11?1:0),12,25)-g).Days)));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYyxCsIwFAB/JWSQhKbBFLpYWoe2ow4iiOOzPNKASSSJLX59rIPTwXHcFMspmpwXCES3AyS8Govy7NfmFkxCRvs5mJgsRFrEFIzTsvdugsRG97YY4PFEecEXboaScUEqmMOV/FdMyztCKDYO8Omqeqflybs0d0od1WHPhapEVfNS818QOedNzl8)

Comment: I don't think this works for the 30th of November...

Comment: Fixed now, I forgot to add a check to if it was December or not

Comment: Are you sure about Month > 25?

Comment: Fixed it now...

Comment: Is the ?1:0 nessesary? doesn't & return an integer?

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>89</s> <s>86</s> <s>84</s> <s>78</s> 76 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to ASCII-only!

```
does[a: now prin"Christmas"while[a/3 * 31 + a/4 <> 397][prin" Eve"a: a + 1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T8lP7U4OtFKIS@/XKGgKDNPyTmjKLO4JDexWKk8IzMnNTpR31hBS8HYUEFbIVHfRMHGTsHY0jw2GqxWwbUsVQmoOREoaRgb@z/tPwA)

Comment: [84](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T8lP7U4OtFKIS@/XD8lsSRVoaAoM0/JOaMos7gkN7FYqTwjMyc1WiNR31jBxk7B0EgzvwjIMQFxjEw1Y6PByhVcy1KVgIYkKmgrGMbG/k/7DwA)

Comment: @ASCII-only Hmm, of course! Thank you!

Comment: [78](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T8lP7U4OtFKIS@/XKGgKDNPyTmjKLO4JDexWKk8IzMnNVojUd9YwUbB0EgzvwjINlGwsVMwMtWMjQarVnAtS1UCak9U0FYwjI39n/YfAA)

Comment: [76](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T8lP7U4OtFKIS@/XKGgKDNPyTmjKLO4JDexWKk0ryQzJxosqOBalqoEVJWooK1gqJGob6xgq2BopJmYlwLkmAA5RqaasbH/0/4DAA)

Comment: @ASCII-only Your 76-byte version does not give correct result when run on Christmas: [Date as an argument](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T@tNC85OjE2uqAoM0/JOaMos7gkN7FYqTSvJDMHIqjgWpaqlGilkKigrWCokahvrGCrYGikmZiXAuSYADlGppqxsf/TgLSuS2qyrpGBocV/AA)
I feel stupid for not using only `now` and not `now/date`. Thank you for your improvements!

Comment: Oh yeah, not that it matters at all, but normally to cross out scores people do <s>score1</s> <s>score2</s> score3 (no commas, strikethrough doesn't reach across scores). Also, yeah that `until` loop is just a `do...while` loop in disguise, huh

Comment: [76?](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T8lP7U4OtFKIS@/XKGgKDNPyTmjKLO4JDexWKk8IzMnNTpR31hBS8HYUEFbIVHfRMHGTsHY0jw2GqxWwbUsVQmoOREoaRgb@z/tPwA)

Comment: @ASCII-only Thanks, nice way to get rid of `or`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 68 bytes

```perl
print"Christmas";print" Eve"while localtime($i++*86400+time)!~/c 25/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRMk5oyizuCQ3sVjJGiKg4FqWqlSekZmTqpCTn5yYU5KZm6qhkqmtrWVhZmJgoA3iayrW6ScrGJnq//8PAA)

Where `c 25` is short for `Dec 25`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-S`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>39</s> 38 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Ð
f
@f1V° UÎ¶B©25¶Uf}a Æ"Eve"Ãi`CËItµs
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVM&code=0ApmCkBmMVawIFXOtkKpMjW2VWZ9YSDGIkV2ZSLDaWBDy0l0tXM)

```
Ð\nf\n@f1V° UÎ¶B©25¶Uf}a Æ"Eve"Ãi`CËItµs
Ð                                            :Create date object for current date
 \n                                          :Assign to variable U
   f                                         :Get date value of U
    \n                                       :Assign to variable V
      @                                      :Function taking an integer X as argument
       f1                                    :  Set the date of U to (modifies U)
         V°                                  :  V, postfix incremented
            UÎ                               :  0-based month value of modified U
              ¶                              :  Check equality with
               B                             :    11
                ©                            :  Logical AND with
                 25¶                         :  Check equality between 25 and
                    Uf                       :    Date value of modified U
                      }                      :End function
                       a                     :Return the first value of X>=0 that returns true
                         Æ                   :Map the range [0,result)
                          "Eve"              :  Literal string
                               Ã             :End map
                                i            :Prepend
                                 `CËItµs     :  Compressed string "Christmas"
                                             :Implicit output joined with spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) -jn, 60 bytes

```
"Christmas",(now|while(gmtime[1:3]!=[11,25];.+86400)|" Eve")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/1/JOaMos7gkN7FYSUcjL7@8pjwjMydVIz23JDM3NdrQyjhW0Tba0FDHyDTWWk/bwszEwECzRknBtSxVSfP//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3Wz8gA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 87 bytes

```lua
w=io.write w'Christmas't=os.time()while os.date('%d%m',t)~='2512'do t=t+86400w' Eve'end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcdBCoAgEADAr3iRLYowqejiKXqI4EILmaBbe@vr1tzmvH2t4igNkolRCWxHpsLRF2CXysAUsWnloBPV3@AZG9BBR@i5fR3YebQQkmLH3bpMxgio/UHAK9T6AQ)