# What year will it be in n seconds?

Tags: code-golf, date

You are given an integer `n` as input, and, regardless of the current date, must return the calendar year (Gregorian calendar, other calendars not allowed) taking place `n` seconds from now.

### Rules

- You may **not** assume that the current year is 2021. In other words, imagine a user testing your solution in five years.
- Standard loopholes forbidden.
- Shortest answer in **bytes** wins.
- Built-in date functions are allowed.
- You must also support negative numbers.
- **On the topic of the year zero: Your answer must follow the ISO specifications, meaning there *is* a year zero.**
- You may assume that the input is always an integer **within bounds of your language number system**.
- If your language's date functions take leap seconds into account, then follow your language, otherwise do not take leap seconds into account.

### Examples (in this case, measured at the time of writing, which is February 15, 2021)

```
100000000000 -> 5190
1000 -> 2021
54398643 -> 2022
54398643234 -> 3744
-100000000000 -> -1148
```

Comment: Is it "local date at 00:00:00" + n seconds or "local date at local time" + n seconds?

Comment: In my case, putting `new Date()` gives the date at my local time,  but that might not be true in other languages. It depends on the language

Comment: If we're using a date type, can we stay within bounds of our language's date system? (e.g. until year 4000 or 9999)?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: Should we use current local time or current Zulu time.

Comment: It depends on the language.

Comment: This rings a bell for me. I can’t find it right now, but I get the feeling that this is a duplicate

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I also figured this would be a duplicate, but then searched for it and found nothing

Comment: Was the negative-number requirement to avoid solutions like `sleep $n;date` being a valid bash answer?  I notice there's no performance requirement :P

Comment: @PeterCordes no, it was for the sake of completeness

Comment: So it was just luck that you managed to exclude that cop-out answer?  I'm curious what you'd think of an answer that sleeps for the specified interval and then prints the current time.

Comment: @PeterCordes well, for one thing you'd die before the first test case :) but seriously, doesn't seem good enough

Comment: It's generally accepted that CodeGolf answers that provably work for large test cases are fine, even if nobody has time to wait for them to finish, so for example O(e^n) or n! time and/or space complexity is fine for a problem that would normally take much shorter, like log(n) time.  But when the "run-time" couldn't be sped up with a faster computer, so it can never produce an answer before the specified time, yeah that's stretching it in my opinion, too.  And a different sort of reason for being slow than the usual excuse.

Comment: Do we have to account for [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)? (I assume we do have to take into account leap years). Note that that would [complicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second#Issues_created_by_insertion_(or_removal)_of_leap_seconds) answers a lot, as they leap seconds are essentially [unpredictable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second#Future_of_leap_seconds)

Comment: @LuisMendo If there are date built-ins for your language, then this depends on your language. If you are coding the date functions yourself, **no**.

Comment: @expressjs123 What if there are date builtins but they do not consider leap seconds?

Comment: @LuisMendo Then you do not need to consider leap seconds

Comment: @expressjs123 Thanks. Please include that in the challenge specification, so people don't have to read the comments

Comment: @LuisMendo Edited the question albeit a bit late

Comment: Does the time reported have to be `n` seconds from when the input was received, or when the output happens? In other words, is it acceptable to take an input `n`, wait `n` seconds, and then output the current year?

Comment: what about daylight saving time? or leap years?

Comment: @JDL Such program is undesirable, I would prefer to see answers which calculate the date in some more complex way than `setTimeout(x=>console.log(Date().getFullYear(),n)`, for example.

Comment: @Agos if your language takes these into account then yes, if not then no. If there are no builtins (see the 05AB1E answer) then preferably yes

Answer (score 21):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 5 bytes

```
υ!+υy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr//3yrovb51sr//3UNDRDgv24KAA)

**Explanation**:

```
υ!+υy
υ!     get the current timestamp in seconds
  +    sum with the implicit input
   υy  get the year from the resulting timestamp
```

Comment: υ is a two byte unicode charicter, so this is 7 bytes. "echo 'υ!+υy' | wc -c" returns 8 including the newline character.

Comment: @timthelion Ohm use a custom [code-page](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm/blob/master/code_page.md) 
as many other languages do, you can read more about it here https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10187/72733

Comment: Wow, haven't seen this language used in a long time! This kind of challenge is exactly what I added the time builtins for, very nice solution!

Answer (score 14):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 16 bytes

```bash
date -d$1sec +%Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifqKGpUP0/JbEkVUE3RcWwODVZQVs18n8tF1eigqEBAkC5QMrUxNjSwszEGIlpZGwC5Okiq/8PAA)

#### Credits

- Saved 12 bytes thanks to @manatwork

Comment: Why not `date -d$1sec +%Y`? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifqKGpUP0/JbEkVUE3RcWwODVZQVs18n8tF1eigqEBAkC5QMrUxNjSwszEGIlpZGwC5Okiq/8PAA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: Sorry, disregard my comment, forgot it's `n` seconds and not 1 second.

Answer (score 13):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 27 bytes

```php
<?=date(Y,time()+$argv[1]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42JbEkVSNSpyQzN1VDU1slsSi9LNowVtP6////hgYIoAAA)

Comment: Oh my, of course! (deletes his own answer in shame)

Comment: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSZvs/LU9DpVjT1i4lsSRVI1KnJDM3VUNTGyj035orNTkjX0ElTUMlsSg9T1NHIcAjIN7V38f6v6EBAnCBOFymJsaWFmYmxnCGkbEJly6yun/5BSWZ@XnF/3XdAA) as a function

Comment: @640KB Nice! It's been a while since I did PHP. Back when I stopped, the Arrow Function RFC was still open. Glad to see it being part of the language now.

Comment: @oktupol yeah but they have strange limitations, such as you cannot do loops in them, or use recursion (without lengthy tricks)

Comment: `<?=date(Y,time()+$argn);` for 24? What's the current consent for $argn? +2 for the flag?

Comment: @Christoph yes, no reason that wouldn't be allowed in this case.  Also, I believe that the consensus is that [flags do not count towards the score](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/command-line-flags-on-front-ends/14339#14339) so using `$argn` would be 24 bytes.

Comment: @Christoph to follow that to the letter you'd need to submit it with `PHP -F` as the language name. Though, there's rarely more than 1 or 2 PHP submissions to a challenge ***[citation needed]*** so I don't tend to see this followed strictly.

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 116 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
"`т‰0Kθ4ÖUD2Qi\28X+ë<7%É31α}"Vžežfžg)IŽª+·÷ÄF©IdiY.V‹i®¬>0ë®1¾ǝDÅsD12‹i>1ë\1Dǝ¤>2}}ǝëć©ić©i<D_-12š31šë®<šDY.Všë®<š]θ
```

Here we go again..

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fKeFi06OGDQbe53aYHJ4W6mIUmBljZBGhfXi1jbnq4U5jw3Mba5XCju5LPbov7ei@dE3Po3sPrdI@tP3w9sMtbodWeqZkRuqFPWrYmXlo3aE1dgaHVx9aZ3ho3/G5Lodbi10MjUAydoaHV8cYuhyfe2iJnVFt7fG5h1cfaT@0MhNM2LjE6xoaHV1obHh0IUizzdGFLkAT4ZzYczv@/9c1NTG2tDAzMQYA) or [try it only with custom specified starting date](https://tio.run/##PYy/S8NAHMX3/hVfAlJLidwlRauETkEo0kGwRSGisXfaA/OD3GXoECiiiP@AW4eCS40UnVoHHe4M2Qr@C/1HYtrBNzx4vM97AXevGC20LqfgQj/mIvCACzcSzL8B4goKIoAwooL6BJgAxiGKfQh8EANXlMTwADSnop0MKDA/jDcEW7cUroPIK5kqIdDpwLBUFbZ56PapTugt85igpLaZV7AJGAFCyCi0y9@71egdHS0XDfXctY1j5hjN07pKrb0t9WTi5Uei9Wrt7Eu@1uVczdX9oZy2CTvb6a1Gn0zO5FsLqVTOsPzOx7Z64DY21k0Lq9TBdj6WLy0jSfKxSn8e5ZRtzLIvdGxkExNnk/XYyiZ2@fgfzpeLotAxapj7zd2G@Qc). (Pretty slow for large inputs, so won't be able to output the larger test cases with the current date.)

**Explanation:**

Since 05AB1E doesn't have any date builtins (except for the current day/time), I've calculated things manually before. I've used the code of going to the next day from [this answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173126/52210), which in turns also uses the leap year calculation of [this answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177019/52210).
Since this challenge also asks to go back in time, I've modified the program accordingly to support that as well.

Step 1: Create a function to calculate the amount of days in a month for a given year/month:

```python
"`т‰0Kθ4ÖUD2Qi\28X+ë<7%É31α}"  # Push this string
                             V # Pop and store it in variable `Y`

 `                             # Pop the list and push all values separated to the stack
                               # (the year will be at the top; month below it)
  т‰                           # Take the divmod-100 of the year
    0K                         # Remove the 0s
      θ                        # Pop and push its last item
       4Ö                      # Check if it's divisible by 4
         U                     # Pop and store this in variable `X`
                               # (X=1 for leap years; X=0 for non-leap years)
          D                    # Duplicate the current month
           2Qi                 # If it's equal to 2 (thus February):
              \                #  Discard the duplicated month
               28X+            #  Push 28 + isLeapYear from variable `X`
             ë                 # Else:
              <                #  Decrease the month by 1
               7%              #  Modulo-7
                 É             #  Modulo-2
                  31α          #  Absolute difference with 31
             }                 # Close the if-else statement
```

Step 2: Now we determine the current date, and loop an amount of times depending on the input:

```python
že                             # Push the current day
  žf                           # Push the current month
    žg                         # Push the current year
      )                        # Wrap all three into a list
       I                       # Push the input-integer
        Žª+                    # Push compressed integer 42300
           ·                   # Double it to 84600 (60*60*24)
            ÷                  # Integer-divide the input by 84600
             Ä                 # Take its absolute value
              F                # And loop that many times:
```

Step 3: If the input was positive, calculate the next date:

```python
©                              #  Store the current date in variable `®` (without popping)
 Idi                           #  If the input is non-negative:
    Y.V                        #   Execute string `Y` as 05AB1E code to get the amount
                               #   of days for the current month/year
       ‹i                      #   If this is smaller than the current days:
         ®                     #    Push the current date again
          ¬                    #    Get its first item (the days)
           >                   #    Increase the day by 1
            0                  #    Push index 0
        ë                      #   Else:
         ®                     #    Push the current date again
          1                    #    Push day=1
           ¾                   #    Push index 0
            ǝ                  #    Insert days=1 at index 0 into the date
             D                 #    Duplicate it
              Ås               #    Pop and push its middle item (the month)
                D              #    Duplicate that month
                 12‹i          #    If it's smaller than 12:
                     >         #     Increase the month by 1
                      1        #     Push index 1
                    ë          #    Else:
                     \         #     Discard the duplicated month
                      1        #     Push month=1
                       D       #     Push index 1
                        ǝ      #     Insert month=1 at index 1 into the date
                         ¤     #     Push its last item (the year)
                          >    #     Increase the year by 1
                           2   #     Push index 2
                    }          #    Close the if-else statement
        }                      #   Close the if-else statement
         ǝ                     #   Insert the value at the given index into the date
```

Step 4: If the input was negative instead, calculate the previous date:

```python
ë                              #  Else (the input is negative):
 ć                             #   Extract head; push [month,year] and day separated
  ©                            #   Store the day in variable `®` (without popping)
   i                           #   If day == 1:
    ć                          #    Extract head; push [year] and month separated
     ©                         #    Store the month in variable `®` (without popping)
      i                        #    If month == 1:
       <                       #     Decrease the [year] by 1
        D                      #     Duplicate it
         _                     #     Check if it's equal to 0 (1 if 0; 0 otherwise)
          -                    #     Subtract that (so we go from year 1 to -1)
           12š31š              #     Prepend 12 and 31: [31,12,year-1-(year-1==0)]
      ë                        #    Else:
       ®<š                     #     Prepend month-1 to the [year] list
          D                    #     Duplicate it
           Y.V                 #     Execute string `Y` as 05AB1E code to get the amount
                               #     of days for this month/year
              š                #     Prepend this to the [month-1,year] list
   ë                           #   Else:
    ®<š                        #    Prepend day-1 to the [month,year] list
```

Step 5: After the loop, extract the year to output:

```python
]                              # Close both the if-else and loop
 θ                             # Pop the date, and only leave its last item (the year)
                               # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tips of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Žª+` is `42300`.

Comment: Oh my. Debugging this must have been fun :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Haha, most of it has been done before in other challenges. But I indeed debugged going to the previous date, since that is new. :)

Comment: Nice, extremely creative. This must have taken a while to write

Comment: @expressjs123 Probably longer than most of the answers indeed. 05AB1E is a code-golf language, so in most challenges one of the shortest. With date-related challenges on the other hand, it's usually one of the longest, since it has to do almost everything manually. But I kinda like doing those kind of challenges in 05AB1E regardless. ;)

Comment: Looks like the tables have turned :P. +1 for doing something like this in a golfing language

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 21 bytes

```ruby
->n{[*Time.now+n][5]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOlorJDM3VS8vv1w7LzbaNLb2f4mCrUI0l4KCoQEC6ChABcAMUxNjSwszE2MUjpGxCVcsV4leamJyhkK1Qk1ejUKBQlp0XqxCLaaoLkj4PwA)

Shorter by a byte than the more obvious `->n{(Time.now+n).year}`.

Comment: The shortest answer I can actually understand! (the APL one is shorter but it's harder to make something of it)

Comment: @expressjs123 I've added an explanation. Let me know if I need to expand on anything.

Comment: Nice. Never even thought about decomposing a `Time` object.

Answer (score 7):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, 27 bytes

```matlab
@(x)datestr(x/86400+now,10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzJbEktbikSKNC38LMxMBAOy@/XMfQQPN/moahAQJockH4INrUxNgSqNYYmW1kbALi6qLo@Q8A)

#### How it works

```matlab
@(x)                          % Define anonymous function with input x
            x/86400           % Divide input by 86400, to convert to days
                    now       % Current time in days since "January 0, 0000"
                   +          % Add 
    datestr(           ,10)   % Convert to string with format 10, which is year
```

Comment: Would the downvoter be so kind to explain how I can improve my answer (other than posting an explanation, which I haven't had the time for yet)?

Comment: Many answers here are getting downvoted without explanation :/

Comment: @Razetime I've seen that happen, sometimes, to answers in golfing languages. Some people don't like those languages and decide that's enough reason to downvote. But Octave?

Comment: not a downvote but it's easy to find a failing input since not all days are 86400 seconds long

Comment: @Agos Good point. I have asked the OP if leap seconds need to be taken into account. Doing it would complicate answers a lot

Comment: OP has confirmed it is not necessary

Comment: @LuisMendo it's not just leap seconds, there's also daylight saving time, leap years...

Comment: @Agos Leap years are taken into account. That's independent from your (correct) claim that "not all days are 86400 seconds long". Daylight saving complications can be circumvented by assuming that the system locale is set to UTC. This type of assumptions are allowed by default; see [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11999/36398) or [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12271/36398); or it could be viewed as a specific [implementation](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5852/36398) of the language. As for your ellipsis sign, I'm not sure what you are referring to

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 42 bytes

```javascript
n=>new Date(+new Date+n*1e3).getFullYear()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i4vtVzBJbEkVUMbxtLO0zJMNdbUS08tcSvNyYlMTSzS0PyfnJ9XnJ@TqpeTn66RpmFogACamgr6@gqmhpYGXJiKgJIwAFRkZGBkiKbI1MTY0sLMxBiqEKLICIciI2MTkDqgImNzE5P/AA)

Comment: Nice answer, but not accepting it yet (waiting a week to accept any answer)

Comment: @expressjs123 For code-golf challenges, we usually do not accept any answer. If you really want to accept one, you should indeed wait _at least_ one week before doing so and pick the shortest one (which is not going to be this one).

Answer (score 6):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <del>32</del> <del>26</del> 23 bytes

```powershell
date|% *dds* @args|% y*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/PyWxJLVGVUErJaVYS8EhsSi9GMir1Pr//7@hAQIAAA)

-3 bytes thanks to mazzy and ZaelinGoodman

Comment: Darnit, I didn't see that somebody already did Powershell before me! I came to almost the same solution, so here's a few bytes for you from mine! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/PyWxJLVGVUErJaVYS0ElsSi9GMir1Pr//7@hAQIAAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: so that the array of `args` does not confuse anyone [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/PyWxJLVGVcExJSVYS8EhsSi9GMir1Pr//7@hAQIAAA "PowerShell – Try It Online") :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <del>74</del> <del>72</del> 65 bytes

```python
lambda x:(date.today()+timedelta(0,x)).year
from datetime import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrBCoQgEADQe1/hcaYNibSlXehPukyoJGSKzCG/fqLze6XxkS8jYd3kpLQ7UvcfHLHXnB01wA/H5J0/mWAcbkTdPNUu1JzU215VMZVcuZdS48UQYLbmt3ytmYxFFHkA)

-7 bytes thanks to @Eric

Comment: According to the rules, you can get rid of the `f=`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrBCoQgEADQe1/hcaYNibSlXehPukyoJGSKzCG/fqLze6XxkS8jYd3kpLQ7Uve/1HgxgCP2mrOjBvjhmLzzJxOMw42om6eKXag5qfe9rGIquXIvAWZrfsvXmslYFHkA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Movatica thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You need to return a year, not print it. So it's allowed to move `print()` to the footer, for 7 fewer bytes. https://tio.run/##FcrBCoQgEADQe1/hcaYNibSlXehPukyoJGSKzCG/fqLze6XxkS8jYd3kpLQ7UvcfHLHXnB01wA/H5J0/mWAcbkTdPNUu1JzU215VMZVcuZdS48UQYLbmt3ytmYxFFHkA

Comment: @EricDuminil thanks!!!

Answer (score 6):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <s>20</s> 15 characters

```
now+.|gmtime[0]
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ jq 'now+.|gmtime[0]' <<< 100000000000
5190
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8vv1xbryY9tyQzNzXaIPb/f0MDBOACcbhMTYwtLcxMjOEMI2MTLl1kdQA)

Comment: Sorry, I totally misinterpreted the question and missed that it's `n` seconds instead of 1 second...

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter), <sup><s>12</s></sup> 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ÐKj +Ue3)i
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=0EtqICtVZTMpaQ&input=MTAwMDAwMDAwMDAw)

-2 bytes from AZTECCO.

This transpiles to the following JS:

```
new Date(K.j() + U * 1e3).i()
```

where `K.j()` is the current time converted to milliseconds, `U` is the input, and `.i()` gets the year from the date constructor.

Comment: `e` can be a number method for [10](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=0EtqICtVZTMpaQ&input=MTAwMDAwMDAwMDAw)

Comment: As Ð is a two byte unicode character, this is actually 11 bytes.

Comment: @timthelion Japt has a custom codepage, just like the 05AB1E answer and Ohm answers do. Click on the "bytes" link to see its encoding.

Answer (score 5):

## R, 12 bytes

```
Sys.time()+n
```

This returns a full date, the year is at the beginning of the string. This is according to the rules, which didn't say to print *just* the year; and this is not in the  [list of "standard loopholes"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) by the time of this answer.

To print *just* a year, R would need 25 bytes:

```
format(Sys.time()+n,"%Y")
```

Comment: Even if you used the `format` solution, you still would have the shortest `R` answer.

Comment: Actually, I think the ISO specification only requires 4-digit years, so you can use `substr(...,1,4)` which is a byte shorter.

Comment: @JDL thanks for the idea! :-) But not sure we can rely that the year will be 4-digit after addition/subtraction? More general `sub("-.*","",Sys.time()+n)` would work but is one char longer.

Comment: @Tomas I don't *think* that matters if you interpret the rules as meaning the output is undefined if it would give rise to a year > 9999. From the wikipedia page: "ISO 8601 prescribes, as a minimum, a four-digit year [YYYY] to avoid the year 2000 problem. It therefore represents years from 0000 to 9999"

Answer (score 3):

## IBM/Lotus Notes Formula Language, <s>34</s> 32 Bytes

```
@Year(@Adjust(@Now;0;0;0;0;0;i))
```

Takes input from a field named `i`. Unfortunately, Formula only supports 32 bit signed integers so it is restricted to a maximum input of +/- 2,147,483,647.

There is no TIO for Formula so here are a couple of screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 11 bytes

```
12L/Z'+10XO
```

Try it out at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=12L%2FZ%27%2B10XO&inputs=54398643&version=22.4.0)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab input as an integer (seconds)
12L     % Push the literal 86400 to the stack (seconds in a day)
/       % Divide the input (in seconds) by the seconds in a day to convert to days
Z'      % Get the current time in days as a float
+       % Add the current time and the seconds in the future together
10XQ    % Determine the year of this date
        % Implicitly display the result
```

Comment: not all days are 86400 seconds long!

Comment: Hey, @Suever, it's been long! :-D Regarding what Agos says, I have asked the OP if leap seconds need to be taken into account (which would be very difficult)

Comment: OP has confirmed it is not necessary

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 38 bytes

```julia
using Dates
f(x)=Year(now()+Second(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc3BCoMwDAbge54ix5YhmLZuenCnvcFOQzzIrKND4rDKfPvOytjY/kvI90Nyn3vX0BLC7B3f8NRM1kMnFllebDMKHp5C7s72OnC7ogxrPXkssQJKv8HyiBkV6YZxUakiyIwu8r3Rb1AfUNpE0wdjIPm/kxCZHGqAbhgxvkPH2/SAax6j46lnEUX@SLdZRbWUYLkNLw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 28 bytes

```
{DateTime.new($_+time).year}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2iWxJDUkMzdVLy@1XEMlXrsEyNbUq0xNLKr9X5xYqaCkEq/waN5Cheo0BZX4WiWFtPwiBRtDAwRQAHEUTE2MLS3MTIzhDCNjEwVdZHV2/wE)

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 30

```
$1=strftime("%Y",$1+systime())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxdC2uKQorSQzN1VDSTVSSUfFULu4shjM19T8/9/QAAG4QBwuUxNjSwszE2M4w8jYhEsXRR0A)

- 5 bytes saved thanks to @manatwork.

Comment: As `strftime()` returns string and in AWK even 0 is truthy as long as it's string, you can reduce it to `$1=strftime("%Y",$1+systime())`, because will always produce output..

Comment: @manatwork thanks! that saves 5 bytes!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 51 bytes

```python
lambda x:gmtime(time()+x).tm_year
from time import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYpBCsIwFAX3PcWjq0RTsSaKLdSLqEjERgP@JIQs0tNH7abOYngML0zp5Z0sBgMu5a3p/tDI/ZOSpZHN4uvMN4lu06hjZaIn/DIsBR/TqhgfkWEdzu12QaCdvVeyOx6UXNZOKoHm/3vtK3wJ0brEskDdnGoBwzLn5QM)

Answer (score 2):

## GNU coreutils (16 bytes)

```
date +%Y -d$1sec
```

Saved 4 bytes, thanks to @ovs.

Comment: You can remove the `onds` from `seconds`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PyWxJFVBWzVSQTdFxbA4Nfn///@6hgYIAAA)

Comment: @ovs ah, I tried `s` and `secs` but missed `sec` somehow, thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a dupe of 2x-1's answer (label for Bash)
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219053/55953

Comment: @CSM really oops. I only looked if someone posted for GNU coreutils, bash slipped my attention.

Comment: @CSM Duplicate answers are [allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/92901).

Answer (score 2):

## MySQL, 35 bytes

`select year(now()+interval [input] second)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 57 bytes

```java
n->java.time.LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(n).getYear()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY9BS8QwEIXv/RVzTIQG11ZRFhcEEYR66l5EPIxpWlLTSWimK4vsb6@xCF481LkMj3nvfUyPB8z75n22Q/AjQ5@0mtg61U6k2XpSZ9ss0w5jhCe0BJ8ZQJjenNUQGTmtg7cNDOkmah4tdS@vgGMX5WIFqDx1e/9I/PDTCO3tTPluQbEdjKq8RnePbPbfivyHkCq4KdZGe2qiIKk6w88GRyHn7VJaHyObQfmJVUhMdiRahSG4411MKLE5/51KyvWh1ebLsri5viqLfwcuinJ1Jv/jj1N2mr8A)

Beats the `Date` API (71 bytes):

```java
n->new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+n*1000).getYear()+1900
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY/BSgMxEIbv@xRzTCobUncVS1EQRBDaU3sR8RC32SVrdhKSSaVIn32NpYIHD@tchpn5v/lnerVXZb97H83gXSDocy0SGSvahA0Zh2K2LIrGqhhhrQzCZwHg05s1DURSlNPemR0MecY2FAx2L6@gQhf5SQqwctht3RPS43kjtLcjlneoP37ZPSjSbHOIpAfRpBA00tYMem2sNZHxC5zNpZRcdJqetQq5M19IOS5PFmfOJRI@X0AWWSuU9/ZwH7Mx@0Z/YsX5dGiy@KquFjfXdfVv4LKqJzPlH38ci@P4BQ)

Note that this one returns the year in absolute form (no negative year).

And I don't even speak about the Calendar API.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 20 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Full program, prompting for `n` from stdin.

```
⊃⊃20 ¯1⎕DT⎕+20⎕DT'J'
```

`20⎕DT'J'` get current local* (**J**uliett) **D**ate**T**ime as UNIX time (code 20; seconds from beginning of 1970)

`⎕+` prompt for `n` and use that to increment the UNIX time.

`20 ¯1` interpret as UNIX times (code 20) and convert to an array of time stamps (code -1)

`⊃` extract the first (and only) time stamp

`⊃` extract the first element (the year)

[Try APL!](https://tryapl.org/?clear&q=%7B%E2%8A%83%E2%8A%8320%20%C2%AF1%E2%8E%95DT%E2%8D%B5%2B20%E2%8E%95DT%27J%27%7D%C2%A810000000000%201000%2054398643%2054398643234%20%C2%AF1000000000&run) (first and last case scaled down by a factor of 10 to avoid hitting date-time limits, 1 January 0001 though 28 February 4000; turned into function for ease of use)

* could also have `'Z'` (**Z**ulu) to use the current UTC time instead of local time.

Comment: I don't really understand APL, so I don't entirely know what the problem is, but when I paste your code into `tryapl` it gives me an error?

Comment: @expressjs123 tryAPL uses a safe version of APL which prevents people from running malicious code, so it'll give you an error for using `⎕`.

Comment: Lots of multibyte unicode characters here, "echo '⊃⊃20 ¯1⎕DT⎕+20⎕DT\'J\'' | wc -c" gives me 32 which after removing the newline makes 31 bytes.

Comment: @timthelion Sorry about that. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 98 bytes

```cs
public class E{public static void m(double x){Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(x).Year);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYyxCgIxEER/JWVSGLS@Ss7r1OYEscwliywkWcnm9CTct8cUgo3TDG94jOWNpQR1Zox3Mb45Q@jqY548WmG9YRZD@SJnk1s9CZ0I0lFbQSyq9BSZPOhrwgxHjCAPJsMFA@gzvfTeuREsRcdyUfoGJqlurX8@TwajVGXQQe62vzR7rR8)

Didn't count the `using System;` and calling function in `Main()`, if they needed to be added, please inform me!

Comment: Still a fine solution, but I kinda doubt whether C# is an appropriate golfing language.

Comment: @expressjs123 C# is a valid golfing language and has been used in many questions, still they are harder to golf

Comment: Can probably cut this down using the C# interactive window..

Comment: You can golf in any language.  I don't normally consider getting the best overall score all that interesting (since many golfing languages can solve a problem in only a couple of bytes) but prefer seeing the best score possible in a language that people use for everyday programming.

Answer (score 1):

## [Visual Basic .NET (VBC)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.12.0/#vbnet-compiler), 89 bytes

```vb
public class E
Shared sub m(x)
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(x).Year)
end Sub
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc69CsIwFAXgPU@RMR0a9BGkdhC0SwRxzM8FL@Sn5CZVnz5WHfQsZ/k4nAWpat8bTWj7CKVfjG2HMKdciKsnFQhtrsaj5dZrIj4yddMZHKdqeBCPjg0pUvIgLxkLHDGC2OsCZwwgp3SXO@cU2BQdrVheQeeOQXRcVdP@pk4ao@jYKIPYbn752hV8enhfaC8)

Answer (score 1):

## VBScript, 52 bytes

```
MsgBox Year(DateAdd("s",Wscript.Arguments(0),Now())
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 43 bytes

```
IntegerPart@DatePlus[#/86400]["YearExact"]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1iamVoSHVCUmVei76Dx3zOvJDU9tSggsajEwSWxJDUgp7Q4WlnfwszEwCA2WikyNbHItSIxuUQpVu2/vkO1oQEC6IA4OqYmxpZA1cZwhpGxiY4usrpazdj/AA)

Thanks to [@LegionMammal978](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/33208/legionmammal978) for hinting that `DatePlus[#/86400][[1,1]]&` fails for negative years

Comment: This fails on negative year numbers.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 oh... you're absolutely right! thanks, guess i'll have to add a few more bytes :-/

Comment: [36 bytes](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/7d8a7d47-e8d0-4541-8c69-d9817d2e2327)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 34 bytes

```cs
x=>DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(x).Year
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5JfmpSTqpOZV2KXZvu/wtbOJbEkNSQzN1XPL79czzElJTg1OT8vpVijQlMvMjWx6L81V1p@UWpicoZGWWKRQrJCZp5CXmp5dKxCtaEBAugoGIJJUxNjSwszE2MEy8jYpFaTK7wosyTVJzMvVUNFqTq5VkHXTqE6TSNZs1ZJ0/o/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html) function, 46

```
to y(s)
(current date+s/60*minutes)'s year
end
```

#### Test driver:

```
repeat with sec in {100000000000, 1000, 54398643, 54398643234, -100000000000}
    log y(sec)
end repeat
```

Save the function and the test driver as text to `nseconds.applescript`, then run in the terminal:

```
osascript nseconds.applescript
```

Or run in the AppleScript Editor app.

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 42 bytes

```sql
select year(dateadd(s,a,getdate()))from t;
```

Uses the standard input method for T-SQL of taking input from a table. You can create a suitable table like this:

```sql
create table t (a int not null);
insert into t values (1000000000), (1000), (54398643), (-1000000000);
```

Note that T-SQL is limited to 32-bit integers for the number of seconds. To avoid that and allow the resulting year to vary between 0 and 9999 costs 6 bytes:

```sql
select year(dateadd(d,a/86400,getdate()))from t;
```

Don't forget to declare `a` as `bigint` if you do this. (Note that hours is represented by `hh` so it's no shorter, and minutes won't let you reach 9999.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Moonscript](https://moonscript.org), <strike>38</strike> 30 bytes

```
(x)->os.date("%Y",os.time()+x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83PzytOLsosKPn/X6NCU9cuv1gvJbEkVUNJNVJJB8gpycxN1dDUrtD8X1CUmVeioAFWBWHjVKupYWiAAJpcJGslUYupibGlhZmJMYnadFFc@R8A)

-8 bytes thanks to ASCII-only

Comment: I'm obviously unfamiliar with Moonscript, but could `x->` be used instead of `(x)->` like in JavaScript?

Comment: Nope, but I did try that, I also try declaring the function name on a different line, as you would with c#, doesn't work.

Comment: doesn't matter; [the lambda is a valid expression](https://tio.run/##y83PzytOLsosKPn//39BUWZeiYKGRoWmrh2EnV@sl5JYkqqhpBqppAPklGTmpmpoaldoamoYGiCAJhfJWknUYmpibGlhZmJMojZdFFf@BwA), so the `a=` is unnecessary.

Comment: also note that the `print ` is also unnecessary.

Comment: @ASCII-only I'm not sure how to turn it into a valid submission that also compiles

Comment: @LiefdeWen no need, you can just state that it's a valid expression without `a=`, and show one example from there to show that it works. the header/footer stuff is mostly for the convenience of automatic byte counting really

Comment: regardless, you can certainly remove the `print` at the very least.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 23 bytes

```perl
$_=gmtime$^T+$_;s/.* //
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jY9tyQzN1UlLkRbJd66WF9PS0Ff//9/QwMEUNC1UzA1tDTgMoRyjAyMDLlMTYwtLcxMjKECRnABI2MTkJixuYkJly66ObqGhiYW//ILSjLz84r/6xbkAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://www.python.org), 53 bytes

```python
from time import*
lambda n:ctime(time()+n).split()[4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehJDM3VSEztyC/qESLKycxNyklUSHPKhkkrAEmNLXzNPWKC3IySzQ0o01i//8HAA)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861), and nice first answer!

Comment: Thank you! Big fan of reading answers on the site, but don't post much.

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 17 bytes

```
:+&Time.now|:year
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWG6201UIyc1P18vLLa6wqUxOLoOIFCm7RhgYIEAsRX7AAQgMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>48</s> 32 bytes

```
func[s][d: now d/9: d/9 + s d/2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzNCoMwEITvPsXgtYjVJKXm0IfoddmD5IcWSpRE6eOnmoPFOezMfLATnc1PZ4krr7Nfg6HEZDXC9IVtB70fXJA27zn7KbrRvJCcAVXY1F3/OkAJSorhfpPiVHoh996c3pjm@A4LaB5t@3F@KfudAurmUeOgvnDFnH8)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/), 57 bytes

```r
library(lubridate)
(function(x)isoyear(now()+seconds(x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchJCsAwCADAe1@i9GKflMWCEBQ0oc3rbec4njmkevENY1WXXibjAffSNsUUXpSwzcVB7QE8g5tpj/8REy4iwvwA) (But the library is not installed on Tio ...)

Comment: invalid, if you use a library it counts as a different language ("R + Lubridate") (as with flags). a link to the library would also be appreciated.

Comment: @ASCII-only thank you for the correction, I added the library to the language specification and its link.

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 34 bytes

```lua
print(os.date('%Y',os.time()+...))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0Qjv1gvJbEkVUNdNVJdB8gpycxN1dDU1tPT09T8//@/rqEBAgAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 21 bytes

```
=YEAR(NOW()+A1/86400)
```

Input is in cell `A1`. Excel dates count by days so we divide by the number of seconds in a day.
Valid dates are in the range 1900-01-00 (that's not a typo) to 9999-12-31.
The screenshot below was taken at 2021-02-16 14:45 UTC.

[image: Screnshot]

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 24 bytes

```
[ seconds hence year>> ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnJiTmpeSWKSQmJycWlycX1SsUJxaWJqaB@QpFBSllpRUFhRl5pUoWHNxVXMpAIGhAQLABcAMUxNjSwszE2MUjpGxCZivi6Kv9n800J7k/LyUYoUMkGUKlamJRXZ2CrH/cxMLFIpLEpOz9f4DAA)

- `seconds` Convert the input to a duration in seconds.
- `hence` The time from now indicated by the duration.
- `year>>` A timestamp is returned by `hence`; we just want the year.