# Anaglot Polygrams

Tags: code-challenge, combinatorics, polyglot, permutations

## Task

Write some code that can be rearranged into n different programs in n different languages each outputting a distinct number from 1 to n.

No two languages should be the same however different versions of "the same language" will be considered distinct languages, as long as they have different major version numbers.  For this challenge REPL environments are not distinct from their parent languages but are still a language.  Each language should run on a distinct permutation of the source code and output a distinct number in the range.

Permutations will be counted in bytes *not in characters*.

You should include each permutation that is run with the language that it is run in for testing purposes.

## Scoring

Your score will be the

[image: Scoring equation]

Where N is the number of languages and L is the number of unique orderings of the programs bytes.

***L is not equal to the length of the program***

<sup><sup>(unless the program is 1 or 0 bytes)</sup></sup>

[Here](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#jcwxCoQwEIXh3lMEqxlRl90yaL93WCzGOAEhO5FEQU8fU2jvaz/en6h39B8nUqKl@/igpCKQ5o2FvSVqAscCEfEVeNoMwyV7fei9OuofQWyN32QFg2hzxahZVOQ1nwZMS5gzWSi/7Jx/uBIxnQ) is a python script to calculate L courtesy of Conor O'Brien.

L is equal to the length of the program factorial if and only if there are no repeated bytes in the program.

The goal is to maximize your score.

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/102646/8478)

Comment: are comments allowed?

Comment: @Adám There would be no reasonable way to ban comments

Comment: So if `#` is the comment symbol in 5 languages, good solution would be `1#2345`

Comment: @Adám that gives you a score of 1/6. I'm sure a score of 1 is easily possible with a 2-byte program (or a 1-byte program for that matter). And adding more digits reduces your score.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_fours maybe? I don't know enough programming languages to work this out for myself but repeating characters doesn't cost you as much in the denominator.

Comment: Does it have to be distinct numbers from 1 to `n`? Can we just output distinct integers?

Comment: @Riker No they have to be 1-n

Comment: You might want to use [this revised script](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#jcwxCoQwEIXh3lMEqxlRl90yaL93WCzGOAEhO5FEQU8fU2jvaz/en6h39B8nUqKl@/igpCKQ5o2FvSVqAscCEfEVeNoMwyV7fei9OuofQWyN32QFg2hzxahZVOQ1nwZMS5gzWSi/7Jx/uBIxnQ), which allows for longer texts to be used

Answer (score 31):

## 34 Languages, 19 bytes, Score: 38,832,018,459,912,437,760,000

Here is a quick answer I threw together to show that it is possible to get an answer scoring better than 1.

```
 12233echo*+--@#..;
```

### 1. NTFJ

```
#*22331+..@o;-- ech
```

This outputs via character code, which is allowed by [meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4719/56656).

[Try it here](https://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/NTFJ/)

### 2. Tcsh

```
echo 2;#..1@2+33*--
```

### 3. 05AB1E

```
2231*+..@echo ;--#3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@29kZGyopa2n55CanJGvYK2rq2z8/z8A)

### 4. Actually

```
@..o; eho1#c3223-*+-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@@@gp5dvrZCakW@onGxsZGSsq6Wt@/8/AA)

### 5. Befunge 98

```
23+.@.21*#3o;-- ech
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#@29krK3noGdkqKVsnG@tq6uQmpzx/z8A)

### 6. Cubix

```
123+23*o@#;-- ech..
```

*Outputs by character code*

[Try it here](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/)

Unfolded code:

```
    1 2
    3 +
2 3 * o @ # ; -
- e c h . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

### 7. Haskell 8 REPL

```
3+2*2 --31#;@..echo
```

### 8. Seriously

```
@..o; eho1#c3223-+*-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/seriously#@@@gp5dvrZCakW@onGxsZGSsq62l@/8/AA)

### 9. ><>

```
33*o;2+..@#12-- ech
```

*Outputs by character code*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@29srJVnbaStp@egbGikq6uQmpzx/z8A)

### 10. Befunge

```
33*1+.@.#22o;-- ech
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#@29srGWoreegp2xklG@tq6uQmpzx/z8A)

### 11. brainbool

```
323*+..@echo ;--#12
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainbool#@29sZKylrafnkJqcka9graurbGj0/z8A)

### 12. 2sable

```
233*+..@echo ;--#12
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/2sable#@29kbKylrafnkJqcka9graurbGj0/z8A)

### 13. Hexagony

```
13;2#2+@*3o-- ech..
```

*Outputs by character code*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/hexagony#@29orGikbKTtoGWcr6urkJqcoaf3/z8A)

Unfolded code:

```
  1 3 ;
 2 # 2 +
@ * 3 o -
 - e c h
  . . .
```

### 14. R

```
12+2#*33..@o; ech
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#@29opG2krGVsrOeQb62rq5CanPH/PwA)

### 15. bc

```
12+3#*23..@o;-- ech
```

### 16. Python 3 REPL

```
13+3#*22..@o;-- ech
```

### 17. irb (Ruby 2.4 REPL)

```
13+2*2#3..@o;-- ech
```

### 18. PowerShell

```
12+2*3#3..@o;-- ech
```

### 19. Python 2 REPL

```
13+2*3#2..@o;-- ech
```

### 20. Python 1.6.1 REPL

```
23-3#-+*21..@o; ech
```

### 21. Ksh

```
echo 21;#..2@3+3*--
```

### 22. Bash

```
echo 22;#..1@3+3*--
```

### 23. Zsh

```
echo 23;#..1@2+3*--
```

### 24. Applescript

```
23+1 --#2*3..@o;ech
```

### 25. Lua REPL

```
23+2 --#1*3..@o;ech
```

### 26. Julia REPL

```
23+3 #2*1..@o;--ech
```

### 27. irb (Ruby 1.9.3 REPL)

```
13*2+3-2 #..@o;-ech
```

### 28. Haskell 7 REPL

```
13*2+2--3#;@.. echo
```

### 29. J

```
echo --1#.23;@+2*.3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@anJGvoKtrqKxnZGztoG2kpWf8/z8A)

### 30. Nim

```
echo 33-2-1;#..@2+2*
```

### 31. fish

```
echo 31;#3-2-..@2+2*
```

### 32. PHP

```
echo 32;#+123*@..--
```

`<?php` is not needed due to [this meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7098/is-the-php-opening-tag-mandatory-in-byte-count/7146#7146)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#@29jX5BRoJCanJGvYGxkraxtaGSs5aCnp6v7/z8A)

### 33. Golfscript

```
3.#.1223*@+o;-- ech
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/golfscript#@2@sp6xnaGRkrOWgnW@tq6uQmpzx/z8A)

### 34. Octave

```
33+1 #22echo*--@..;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@29srG2ooGxklJqcka@lq@ugp2f9/z8A)

Comment: And that's why I hate REPL-capable languages

Comment: If you add `.` and another language, you can have 11. J: `2#.2+3*3`

Comment: @WheatWizard [here](https://tio.run/nexus/j)

Comment: @WheatWizard [FWIW, all valid J permutations](https://tio.run/nexus/j#HY3RCoMgAEXf/Yq7hKUbuMw3o3DfsSdxgrGoIS6IQb/ubE/3cDhws50m9BqjMCfcRVni10MoaDQESHETqAS2ws4mFwSiT584Hy2af@PnpyCceBeWSmIAozuY7B@ayvN7dC9uBg7Wwa8c3rqA7gb23VG@DeWo21apK73UOf8A "J – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @WheatWizard J is technically a REPL. Prefix the code with `echo ` to see the output.

Comment: Nice! +1 BTW, [I am not too behind](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119820/anaglot-polygrams/119885#119885)! :)

Comment: Even more TIO links: [Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#KyjKzCvR@G9orG2srGVkpOeQb62r@1/zPwA), [Python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#KyjKzCuJ@W9orG2kZaxspOeQb62r@/8/AA), [zsh](https://tio.run/nexus/zsh#@5@anJGvYGRsraxn6GCkbaylq/v/PwA),
 [Lua](https://tio.run/nexus/lua#KyjKzCvR@G9krG2koKurbKhlrOeQb52anPFf8z8A), [Julia](https://tio.run/nexus/julia#KyjKzCvR@G9krG2soGykZajnkG@tq5uanPFf8z8A), [Ruby](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#KyjKzCuJ@W9krGykZaxtqOeQb62r@/8/AA), [Haskell](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@bmJlnW1CUmVeiYWisZaRtpKmra6xs7aCnkJqckf//PwA) (not sure how to do this one)

Comment: Also [ksh](https://tio.run/nexus/ksh#@5@anJGvYGRoraxn5GCsbaylq/v/PwA), [bash](https://tio.run/nexus/zsh#@5@anJGvYGRkraxn6GCsbaylq/v/PwA) (also not sure about the ruby one in the last comment, probably the wrong version)

Comment: `echo+32;#123*@.-- ` PHP anyone?

Comment: Will you stop, please !!!! No one can beat that, never!

Comment: @WheatWizard We usally don't use the tags when golfing (only if we use it to output like `<?=`) because you can run code using `php -r` without the tags. There's some meta for that if I find the time I will link it.

Comment: @WheatWizard Relevant [meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7146/29637).

Comment: [jelly 35](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/B0Cg1OV9LV9dBWU/POsPYSNv4/38A), [Vyxal 36](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCIyMSAzLTIqIzNlY2hvKy1ALi47IiwiIiwiIl0=)

Answer (score 12):

## 1 language, 0 bytes, score 1

I don't know how high scores will get in this challenge, so let's take this spot.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina)

In Retina, the empty program with no input prints `1`.

Score = 1!/0! = 1/1 = 1

Comment: This looks at first glance like a joke answer, but has the highest score so far...

Comment: Same score for a 1 byte single language  entry, no?

Comment: @Adám  yeah, like `1` in R, for example

Comment: @Giuseppe Or any other language that outputs numbers without any specific command like `echo` or `print`.

Comment: In jelly, this outputs `0`, so 2 languages => score=2

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder No that is not how the scoring works.  You must output 1 through n and each should be on a separate permutation.

Comment: Where's your TIO link?

Comment: Um, the score is infinity (or `NaN`), not 1.

Comment: @Steve Nope.  The number of permutations of a length 0 program is 0! = 1.

Comment: Oh, I just learnt something, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

### 2 languages, 2 bytes, score 1

Doesn't beat Leo's answer, but I thought I'd present a 2-language solution (well, and Wheat Wizard ninja'd a score-2 answer in between anyway).

#### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), prints `1`

```
2`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@2@U8P8/AA)

This is essentially the same as Leo's empty program.

#### [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), prints `2`

```
`2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#@59g9P8/AA)

This is `repr(2)` so it computes `"2"` which gets printed as `2`.

Answer (score 5):

## 26 languages, 46 bytes, Score : 1.68861953e-28 (0.000000000000000000000000000168861953)

All the languages are mainstream ones (i.e. they are actually used by people in development) and there's no REPL solution in any language. This answer is never going to win, but that's not a reason for not posting it...

```
//#**print()ale123456789+chous :f{}:""enttd *;
```

---

### 1. Python 2

```
print 1#//**()alechous:f{}:23456789+ ""enttd*;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19QlJlXomCorK@vpaWhmZiTmpyRX1pslVZda2VkbGJqZm5hqa2gpJSaV1KSomX9/z8A)

### 2. Python 3

```
print(2)#//**alechous13456789+: f{}: ""enttd*;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@19QlJlXomGkqayvr6WVmJOanJFfWmxobGJqZm5hqW2lkFZda6WgpJSaV1KSomX9/z8A)

### 3. Ruby

```
puts 3#//**()alecho:f12456789+{}rin: ""enttd*;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@19QWlKsYKysr6@lpaGZmJOanJFvlWZoZGJqZm5hqV1dW5SZZ6WgpJSaV1KSomX9/z8A)

### 4. CoffeeScript

```
alert 4#//**()pinchous:12356789+f{}: ""enttd*;
```

[Try it online!](https://jsfiddle.net/MangaCoder/n77t31fv/)

### 5. PHP

```
echo 5/*alrt#()pinus:f{:12346789+} ""enttd;**/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#@29jX5BRoJCanJGvYKqvlZhTVKKsoVmQmVdabJVWbWVoZGxiZm5hqV2roKSUmldSkmKtpaWvYG/3/z8A)

### 6. Perl 5

```
print 6#/*ale()chous:12345789+f{:} */""enttd*;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#@19QlJlXomCmrK@VmJOqoZmckV9abGVoZGxiam5hqZ1WbVWroKWvpJSaV1KSomX9/z8A)

### 7. Perl 6

```
print 7#/*ale)(chous:f12345689+{:} */""enttd*;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#@19QlJlXomCurK@VmJOqqZGckV9abJVmaGRsYmpmYaldbVWroKWvpJSaV1KSomX9/z8A)

### 8. JavaScript (ES5)

```
alert(8)//pin 12345679+#*chous:f{:} *""enttd*;
```

[Try it online!](https://jsfiddle.net/MangaCoder/zunpgLjf/)

### 9. JavaScript (ES6)

```
alert(9)//inp 12345678+#*chous: f{:}*""enttd*;
```

[Try it online!](https://jsfiddle.net/MangaCoder/chnrvp6a/)

### 10. JavaScript (ES7)

```
alert(9+1)//pni #*chous2345678: f{:}*""enttd*;
```

[Try it online!](https://jsfiddle.net/MangaCoder/1y9a4t96/)

### 11. Batch

```
echo 9+2 ::alrt()//pni#*usf{1345678}*""enttd*;
```

*Couldn't find an online interpreter for this one. Try running this code in the Command Prompt, if you are on Windows.*

### 12. Bash

```
echo 12 #::alrt(3456789+)//pni*usf{}*""enttd*;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@anJGvYGikoGxllZhTVKJhbGJqZm5hqa2pr1@Ql6lVWpxWXaulpJSaV1KSomX9/z8A)

### 13. CSS

```
*:after{content:"13" /*h# l(2456789+)pisud;*/}
```

[Try it online!](https://jsfiddle.net/MangaCoder/x0p433tw/)

### 14. Less

```
*:after{content:"14" /*#h l(2356789+)pisud;*/}
```

[Try it online!](http://jsbin.com/bevecu/edit?output)

### 15. Stylus

```
*:after{content:"15" /*#hl (2346789+)pisud;*/}
```

[Try it online!](http://jsbin.com/nukedid/edit?output)

### 16. TypeScript

```
alert(16)//inp #*chous2345789+: :{f}*""entt*d;
```

[Try it online!](https://jsfiddle.net/MangaCoder/w5cv3og7/)

### 17. Octave

```
disp(17)#//n *chou2345689+: :{f}*""entt*alert;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@5@SWVygYWiuqayvn6eglZyRX2pkbGJqZmGpbaVgVZ1Wq6WklJpXUqKVmJNaVGL9/z8A)

### 18. Swift

```
print(18)//ds# *chou2345679+: :{f}""ent*ale*t;
```

[Try it online!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59140de7cfa69e773dc97e38)

### 19. Julia

```
print(19)#ds// *chou2345678+: :{f}""ent*ale*t;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#@19QlJlXomFoqamcUqyvr6CVnJFfamRsYmpmbqFtpWBVnVarpJSaV6KVmJOqVWL9/z8A)

### 20. Maxima

```
print(18+2);/*#ds ouch 345679::{f}""entale*t*/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/maxima#@19QlJlXomFooW2kaa2vpZxSrJBfmpyhYGxiamZuaWVVnVarpJSaV5KYk6pVoqX//z8A)

### 21. Clojure

```
(print "21");/*#ds ouch3456789+::{f}entale*t*/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/clojure#@69RUJSZV6KgZGSopGmtr6WcUqyQX5qcYWxiamZuYaltZVWdVpuaV5KYk6pVoqX//z8A)

### 22. Groovy

```
print 19+3//();*#ds oh245678::{fuc*}entalet*""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/groovy#@19QlJlXomBoqW2sr6@haa2lnFKskJ9hZGJqZm5hZVWdVpqsVZuaV5KYk1qipaT0/z8A)

### 23. CommonLisp

```
(print 23);//*#ds oh1456789+::{fuc*}entalet*""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/clisp#@69RUJSZV6JgZKxpra@vpZxSrJCfYWhiamZuYaltZVWdVpqsVZuaV5KYk1qipaT0/z8A)

### 24. EmacsLisp

```
(print 24);//*#ds oh1356789+::{fuc*}entalet*""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/emacs-lisp#@69RUJSZV6JgZKJpra@vpZxSrJCfYWhiamZuYaltZVWdVpqsVZuaV5KYk1qipaT0/z8A)

### 25. PicoLisp

```
(print 25);//*#ds oh1346789+::{fuc*}entalet*""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/picolisp#@69RUJSZV6JgZKppra@vpZxSrJCfYWhsYmZuYaltZVWdVpqsVZuaV5KYk1qipaT0/z8A)

### 26. Logo

```
print 21+5 ;//*#dsoh346789::{fuc*}entalet*""()
```

[Try it online!](http://www.calormen.com/jslogo/)

Comment: And Swift, displaying 18: `print(18)//#**alechous: f{}:2345679+ ""enttd*`

Comment: Suppose this will increase your score by about 0.002e-20 :))

Comment: pfft. 2017 will be the year of the Befunge Web Framework!

Comment: Comments are just going to turn this entire question into insanity…

Comment: btw Applescript which can be seen in my answer works without a REPL, but does require `--` for comments.  If you add `--` you can probably also work in at least one type of haskell.

Comment: You also don't need all the characters you have `6` can be replaced with `2*3` in the first instance and `8*2` when it is being used to make 16.  You could probably do the same with some of the other digits.  (I see you have already dumped `0`)

Comment: Right now I think you should aim to minimize the number of characters in your source, removing a single character will currently multiply your score by 44.  Grouping characters is also not a bad idea, In my answer I repeat `2` and `3` because repeats contribute less to the count.

Comment: Ruby has `print` btw, so you don't need the `u` from the `puts`.  If you use `printf` in bash and `print` in batch, you can also get rid of some characters there. (`cho`)

Comment: @WheatWizard Thank you so much for the suggestion (and the upvote! :)) But, unfortunately, I can't implement them. Doing so will require me to update all the TIO links that I have linked to in my answer before reading your comments, as well as updating all the solutions. I, currently, don't posses enough potential to perform that! Sorry (and thanks for the upvote; that really lifted my spirits; as I was thinking "What the hell did I add those 9 more languages and revised TIO links for?!") I hope you'll understand my predicament! Sorry (and thanks for the upvote!), once again! :) Thanks for....

Comment: ....reading such long comment too! :) @WheatWizard

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks for that! Added it! Along with it, I have added 8 more languages too (excluding Swift)! But that only made my score worse! :p

Comment: @Mathime Added 9 more languages! Have a look!

Comment: @Skyler I don't get what you mean! Could you explain, please! Sorry, if it's too obvious! :p

Answer (score 3):

### 12 Languages, 16 Bytes - Score: 0.003

```
print(0b11000)#1
```

Prints `1` in **2sable**

```
print(0b1100)#10
```

Print `10` in **05AB1E**

```
print(0b11)#1000
```

Re-arranging the binary numbers prints 2-9, 11-12 in:

- Crystal
- Julia 0.5
- J-uby
- Lily
- Perl 5
- Perl 6
- Python 3
- Python 2
- Python
- Ruby

L=145297152000
12! = 479001600

I just used TiO for a list of valid languages for this (If these are all considered unique?).  Removed some duplicate languages thanks to input from Wheat Wizard.  This answer is looking pretty low, though I feel it has potential.

Comment: Julia 0.4 and 0.5 have the same major version number.  And so does Python 2 (PyPy) and Python 2.  However this will probably work in Python 1

Comment: Can you leave off the print and call it repl? How many of these have repls?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Lily, Perl, and Crystal do not have repls.  All the other ones do.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), Python 2, Python 3, Japt, 4.735e-15

```
# ()//1234=>inprt
```

### ES6 (1)

```
p=>1//rint 234()#
```

### Python 2 (2)

```
print 2#134=>//()
```

### Python 3 (3)

```
print(3)# 124=>//
```

### Japt (4)

```
#rint>=3/2)p (4/1
```

Comment: Your score is `4.73508590206e-15` btw.

Comment: Is it? 4 factorial is 24. That divided by 17 is roughly 1.4

Comment: Not divided by 17 but by 5068545850368000, the number of ways to rearrange the string.

Comment: Oops. Misread that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @WheatWizard Ouch, I missed that too.

Comment: I don't know how it would affect the Japt answer, but you could switch Python2 to print `1` with `4/3` to save 1 byte

Comment: As I calcuated, your score is actually 1,3495e-13, because there are 177843714048000 permutations according to the script provided.