# Summation from a to b

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic

The program has an input of a and b, and outputs the sum of numbers from a to b, inclusive. Score is in bytes. As always, [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed.

If your input is in the format [a,b], +3 bytes

Comment: Can `b` be smaller than `a`, and if so, what should the output be?

Comment: If `b` is greater than or equal to `a` There's a closed-form solution to this problem: `(b-a+1)*(b+a)/2`

Comment: Can we take input as a two-element list?

Comment: 4 hours, 25 answers and 46 answer votes after posting, you change it so that b>a must error? Ugh. Is that an allowed codegolf thing? (I guess that's a wrong change as well - or is it intended to be a countdown now?)

Comment: You are penalizing people for taking input in the format of [a,b]? Why? How does this improve the question?

Comment: B/c [a,b] uses 2 more bytes than a b

Comment: The overwhelming consensus regarding [defaults for reading several pieces of input](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5437/12012) is that two integers can be read in list from with no penalty. You can obviously override those defaults in your challenge, but it would be preferable to do so when posting the question, not 5 hours later. In case you didn't know, we have a [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140) where you can get feedback from the community and iron out the details before posting the actual challenge.

Comment: @Hurricane996 `[a,b]` in concept doesn't always use 2 more bytes than `a b`. What's meant is a list/vector/pair/whatever you want to call it, which doesn't have to look like `[a,b]`. Such a collection is a more convenient means of input in some languages rather than two separate inputs.

Comment: If I were to make a program in brainf***, how would I take input?

Comment: -1 because of numerous modifications.

Answer (score 24):

## [Stuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Stuck), 4 Bytes

I'm amazed Stuck finally is winning something! The inclusive range function checks to see if the top of the stack is a list of length 2, and uses it for the parameters of the range function if so.

```
t]R+
```

Input is `|` separated, as `t` takes a bunch of inputs separated by `|`s and places them on the stack. `]` just wraps the elements in a list, and lets the range function do it's job.

If that still falls in the penalty, then this works (5 Bytes): `ii]R+`

Comment: Dammit. I was going to try to make a Stuck solution but the docs on Esolang didn't say that you could use the inclusive range function like that and so I gave up....

Comment: @quartata Sorry, I haven't updated the docs in a while.. :P

Answer (score 13):

## Pyth, <s>6</s> <s>4 bytes + 3 = 7</s> 5 bytes

```
s}vzQ
```

Avoids the 3-byte penalty imposed by the new input requirements via an extra byte.

Takes input separated from stdin separated by newlines.

[Live demo.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%7DvzQ&input=1%0A3&debug=1)

Answer (score 10):

### Python, 26

```python
lambda a,b:(a+b)*(b-a+1)/2
```

Assumes `b>=a`. Uses the formula of `mean * #summands`. The result is a whole number, so it doesn't matter if the `/` is Python 2's floor division.

Shorter by 2 chars than the direct expression

```python
lambda a,b:sum(range(a,b+1))
```

Comment: I feel like there should be a char save with `~`. Expanding gives the same length `(b*b-a*a+a+b)/2`. So is `-b*~b/2-a*~-a/2`.

Comment: What about `(a-a*a-~b*b)/2`?

Answer (score 8):

## Matlab/Octave, 14 bytes

```
@(a,b)sum(a:b)
```

Answer (score 8):

## Julia, 15 bytes

```julia
s(a,b)=sum(a:b)
```

This creates a function `s` that sums the range `a:b`. This assumes `a` ≤ `b`.

Comment: Upvote for a short answer that is completely legible.

Answer (score 8):

## Dyalog APL, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
+÷2÷1--
```

This is a dyadic function train which is equivalent to

```
{(⍺+⍵)÷2÷1-⍺-⍵}
```

[Try it online.](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190+%F72%F71--%20%u22C4%201%20f%2010&run)

#### How it works

```
        ⍝ Left argument: a, right argument: b
      - ⍝ Calculate a-b.
    1-  ⍝ Subtract the difference from 1 to calculate 1-(a-b) = b-a+1.
  2÷    ⍝ Divide 2 by the difference to calculate 2/(b-a+1).
+       ⍝ Calculate a+b.
 ÷      ⍝ Divide the sum by the quotient to calculate (a+b)/(2/(b-a+1)),
        ⍝ i.e., (a+b)(b-a+1)/2.
```

Answer (score 7):

## Javascript ES6, 21 bytes

```
a=>b=>(a+b)*(b-a+1)/2
```

Used the same approach to that problem that's almost everywhere: "Add up all of the numbers between 1 and 100, inclusive."

Comment: I didn't know you could use lambda's in Javascript!

Comment: Oh, it's in the new ES6 specs.

Comment: You can save a byte with currying (`a=>b=> …`)

Answer (score 6):

## Java, <s>44</s> 42 bytes

An approach I haven't seen here so far: Via gaussian sums you can derive that the sum of all numbers from `a` to `b` is `(b-a+1)*(b+a)/2`

If you only have to implement a function, you could do it in 42 bytes:

```
int s(int a,int b){return(b-a+1)*(b+a)/2;}
```

The conventional approach is 3 bytes longer:

```
int s(int a, int b){for(;b>a;a+=b--);return a;}
```

A full program is 142 bytes:

```
public class S{public static void main(String[]a){int n=Integer.parseInt(a[0]),m=Integer.parseInt(a[1]);System.out.println((m-n+1)*(m+n)/2);}}
```

Comment: You really should try something other than Java. ;)

Comment: Would it work to remove the space in `int a, int b`? Perhaps the space after `return` as well?

Comment: @AlexA. Thanks=) Do you know about the Java8 lambdas? I haven't installed it yet but I think `(int a,int b)->(b-a+1)*(b+a)/2` should work as a lambda?

Comment: Even without lambdas, `public static` isn't usually required for functions here. Just `int s(...args...)` is fine for the signature.

Comment: you could reduce it by 3 characters, if you use `long` instead `int`, i'm talking about full program here

Comment: I know it's been almost 2 years ago.. But, the conventional approach is 4 bytes longer, not 3 (after you've removed the space at `int a,int b`. The full class can be **118 bytes**: `class S{public static void main(String[]a){long n=new Long(a[0]),m=new Long(a[1]);System.out.print((m-n+1)*(m+n)/2);}}`. And all three can be lowered if you use Java 8: `a->b->(b-a+1)*(b+a)/2` (**21 bytes**); `a->b->{for(;b>a;a+=b--);return a;}` (**34 bytes**); and `interface S{static void main(String[]a){long n=new Long(a[0]),m=new Long(a[1]);System.out.print((m-n+1)*(m+n)/2);}}` (**115 bytes**)

Answer (score 6):

## APL, 9 bytes

```
-⍨/2!⎕+⍳2
```

Takes input as a two-element list . Set your index origin to 0 (`⎕IO←0`) before running.

This is longer than the [answer by @Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60139/39328) but in my opinion more stylish.

It calculates `(B+1 nCr 2)-(A nCr 2)` = `B(B+1)/2-A(A-1)/2`.

Comment: Does `⍨` actually take only one byte in some encoding?

Comment: @RobertoBonvallet I believe APL uses a special encoding

Answer (score 6):

## TI-BASIC, 8 bytes

```
mean(Ans+Ansmin(ΔList(Ans
```

Takes input in the form `{A,B}`.

```
                      Ans    ; {A,B}
                ΔList(       ; {B-A}
            min(             ;  B-A
         Ans                 ; (B-A)*{A,B}
     Ans+                    ; (B-A+1)*{A,B}
mean(                        ; (B-A+1)*(A+B)/2
```

By comparison, the shortest two-variable solution is 11 bytes:

```
Prompt A,B
sum(randIntNoRep(A,B   ;random permutation of integers between, inclusive
```

Answer (score 6):

### SH, 16 bytes

```
seq $1 $2|numsum
```

Where $1 and $2 are the values of two args passed to this program on the command line. numsum is from the num-utils package. Another version that is also 16 bytes is:

```
seq -s+ $1 $2|bc
```

Answer (score 5):

### CJam, 7 bytes

```
q~),>:+
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~)%2C%3E%3A%2B&input=5%208)

```
q~  e# Read and eval input, pushing a and b onto the stack.
),  e# Increment b and turn into the range [0 1 2 ... b-1 b].
>   e# Discard the first a elements to get [a a+1 ... b-1 b].
:+  e# Reduce + onto the list, computing the sum.
```

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 9 bytes

```
Tr@*Range
```

This evaluates to an unnamed function taking two integers. I was going to use the built-in `Sum`, but it's 4 bytes longer:

```
x~Sum~{x,##}&
```

Answer (score 5):

### [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 14 bytes

This assumes that the stack has already been populated with `a` and `b`, so this is basically a function. I'm using [this online interpreter](http://fishlanguage.com/playground) which lets you put values onto the stack before the program runs. An extra three bytes for `-v` (plus a space, for running from a terminal) would put this answer at **17 bytes**.

```
:r:@-1+@+*2,n;
```

#### Explanation:

```
-v  ab                 (initial stack)
:   abb                duplicates top of stack (b)
r   bba                reverses stack
:   bbaa               duplicates top of stack (a)
@   baba               rotates top three elements clockwise (baa -> aba)
-   ba,(b-a)           subtraction (ba -> b-a)
1+  ba,(b-a+1)         adds 1 (b-a -> b-a+1)
@   (b-a+1),ba         rotates top three elements clockwise
+   (b-a+1),(b+a)      addition (ba -> b+a)
*   (b-a+1)*(b+a)      multiplication
2,  (b-a+1)*(b+a)/2    division by 2 (/ is a mirror, so , is used instead)
n;  <integer, quit>    output top of stack as an integer and quit
```

This assumes that `0 <= a <= b` and uses this closed-form solution `(b-a+1)(b+a)/2` to directly calculate the answer.

---

This code below goes the route of trying to be a full program, but only works for `0 <= a <= b <= 9`. That you have to do integer parsing in ><> is annoying. Thanks to **Cole**, if we assume the input is two single digits, then four bytes can be shaved off. **20 bytes.**

```
ic%:ic%:@$-1+@+*2,n;
```

The trick is that instead of `68*-`, use `c%` (take the modulus with respect to `12`). This will indeed work because `48+x (mod 12)` is `x (mod 12)`, which is 0-9 if `x` is 0-9.

Comment: For your second program, you can shave off some bytes by changing `68*-` to `c%` since we only expect input from 0 to 9. EDIT: also, division is `,`, not `/`.

Comment: It was not originally clear to me where the number 48 was coming from.  I see now that it's because the ASCII codes for the characters 0 through 9 are 48 through 57, but I'm mentioning it in case someone else is mystified.

Answer (score 5):

## R - 24 Bytes

```
f=function(a,b) sum(a:b)
```

Comment: You can save yourself 3 by making it an unnamed function and remove the space from it.

Comment: You can save 1 byte because you don't really need the space. Also, is it really necessary to declare a function? I see a lot of submissions that doesn't have them so I am getting  confused about it.

Comment: @AndréMuta Submissions on this site have to use one of our standard input formats. That means that `a` and `b` can be function arguments (as is the case here), they can come from user input like from `scan()`, or they can be read as command line arguments.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 13 bytes

```
x#y=sum[x..y]
```

Usage example: `10 # 12` -> `33`

Answer (score 4):

## O, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
Hjmr]+o
```

Explanation

```
H   Start an array with a number from input
 j  Get input as number
 mr Range between 
]   
+   Sum the array
o   print it
```

Try it [here](http://o-lang.herokuapp.com/link/code=Hjmr%5D%2Bo&input=10%0A12)

Comment: I was trying an O answer, but I forgot about `mr` and ended up with some REALLY long crap. +1

Answer (score 4):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>32</s> 30 bytes

```
([{({}[()])}{}]{()({}[()])}{})
```

[Try it online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KFt7KHt9WygpXSl9e31deygpKHt9WygpXSl9e30p&input=NSAxMg)

### Explanation

This uses the triangulation algorithm to calculate `T(a-1)` and `T(b)` then pushes the difference.  I actually golfed 2 bytes off the existing world record triangulation algorithm while making this solution.

To push `T(a-1)` it uses a modified version of the original algorithm.  Instead of the simple:

```
({}[()])({()({}[()])}{})
```

I removed both the first `({}[()])` and the `()`.

The reason `()` was there in the first place was that `({({}[()])}{})` quite conveniently calculates `T(n-1)` for us so there is no need to decrement if we remove the `()`

This first portion is made negative and put next to the second portion which performs standard triangulation inside of the outer push.

```
([{({}[()])}{}]{()({}[()])}{})
```

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell, <s>32</s> <s>31</s> 29 Bytes

```
$args-join'..'|iex|measure -s
```

Thanks to [TessellatingHeckler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/571/tessellatingheckler) for the alternate way to make a range and sum it. Works for any combination of `a` and `b` so long as the difference between them is less than 50,000.

---

Previous version (31):

```
param($a,$b)($b-$a+1)*($b+$a)/2
```

Uses the same formula as others, assumes that `b>=a`.

---

Previous version (32):

```
param($a,$b)($a..$b)-join'+'|iex
```

Pretty trivial. Generates a range of numbers from `$a` to `$b`, `-join`s them with a `+`, then pipes that to `Invoke-Expression` which performs the summation. Yay verbosity. *Note:* This function will break if the two numbers are > 50,000 apart, as that's the (hard-coded) limit of dynamically generated ranges in PowerShell, *but* it correctly handles `b<a`, so, y'know...

Comment: I'll throw in `$f={$args-join'..'|iex|measure -s}` used like `& $f 5 10 -> 45` - measuring just the inner function content as you are, it hits **29** bytes. The rules don't say it must *only* output the sum. Cool idea with the join/iex,

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Oh, interesting. Note that you don't need the `$f={ }` if you save it as a ps1 file and execute it as a script from the PS command line. Same with the `param()` versions. That's why I've only ever measured "just the inner function content" because it's a complete program.

Answer (score 3):

### [Befunge](http://www.esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge)-93, <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
&:1-*&:1+*\-2/.@
```

#### Explanation

```
&   a                      input as integer (a)
:   aa                     duplicate top of stack (a -> a,a)
1-  a,(a-1)                subtract 1 from top of stack (a -> a-1)
*   a*(a-1)                multiply top two values of stack (a,a-1 -> a*(a-1))
&   a*(a-1),b              input as integer (b)
:   a*(a-1),bb             duplicate top of stack (b -> b,b)
1+  a*(a-1),b,(b+1)        add 1 to top of stack (b -> b+1) 
*   a*(a-1),b*(b+1)        multiply top two values of stack (b,b+1 -> b*(b+1))
\   b*(b+1),a*(a-1)        swap top two values of stack (c,d -> d,c)
-   b*(b+1)-a*(a-1)        subtract top two values of stack (d,c -> d-c)
2/  (b*(b+1),a*(a-1))/2    divide top of stack by 2
.@  <output, exit>         output as integer and stop
```

This uses the following formula:

```
b(b+1)   (a-1)(a-1+1)   b(b+1) - a(a-1)
------ - ------------ = ---------------
  2            2               2
```

Unfortunately, the shorter `(b-a+1)(b+a)/2` cannot be done in Befunge easily because it requires accessing `b` and `a` twice, which is impossible to do when working only with the top two values of the stack. Storing a value in "memory" would take more characters.

Answer (score 3):

## C++, 42 bytes

As a function (42 bytes):

```cpp
int s(int a,int b){return(a+b)*(b-a+1)/2;}
```

As a full program that reads from STDIN and writes to STDOUT (86 bytes):

```cpp
#include<iostream>
main(){int a,b;std::cin>>a;std::cin>>b;std::cout<<(a+b)*(b-a+1)/2;}
```

Both approaches compute the sum using the Gaussian formula.

Ungolfed:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int s(int a, int b) {
    return (a + b) * (b - a + 1) / 2;
}

int main() {
    int x, y;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cin >> y;
    std::cout << s(x, y) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Try it online](http://goo.gl/64Z7tt)

Comment: You can save few bytes if you use lambda instead. Requires changing tag to `C++11` though.

Comment: @Zereges I don't know much about C++ lambdas. Would it be something like `[](int a,int b){return(a+b)*(b-a+1)/2;}`?

Comment: yes, exactly like that. Sorry, but I for some reason can address this post to you using `@`

Comment: @Zereges You don't need to ping me since this is my post; I'll always get notified of a comment on it. And thanks! :)

Comment: You can save 9 bytes from the full program by using `std::cin>>a>>b;` to get your inout from one line with a space in the middle (eg `1 10`)

Comment: hehe, 42 bytes => +1!!

Answer (score 3):

## Rust, 27 bytes

Creates a closure `s` that takes two unsigned 8-bit integers and returns another.

```
let s=|m,n|(n-m+1)*(m+n)/2;
```

Answer (score 3):

## Jelly, 2 bytes

```
rS
```

[Try it online.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=clM&input=&args=NQ+MTA)

```
r   Yields inclusive range [a, b]
 S  Sum
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 19 bytes

```
a->b->a-a*a-b*~b>>1
```

*Thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904)*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU6xCsIwEN3zFRnbQoKdqwEXwUEcipM4XGtbUtMkJNdCkfrrNWIRcfAt9@7uvXvXwgCsvd5m2VnjkLah5z1KxetelyiN5nuNu4Vn5K/spMGNR1s5QOMyQmxfKFnSUoH39ABS0zuhAcvcI2Aog5FX2oVtlKOTujlfKLjGx4v4ha8X1r85gtabGZgomAAGCbAieRRCpHP2seejx6rjpkduQwIqHdUcrFVjlMZvsvXhbpSu4vhtm8g0PwE)

### Explanation

Expand the numerator:

$$(a+b)*(b-a+1) = a*b - a*a + a + b*b - a*b + b = b * b - a * a + a + b$$

`>> 1` is equivalent to divide by `2`, but it has lower precedence than addition and subtraction, so no parentheses are required. `~x` is the same as `-x - 1`. Thus,

```
a-a*a-b*~b>>1 = (a-a*a-b*(-b-1))/2
              = (a-a*a+b*b+b)/2
              = (b*b-a*a+a+b)/2
```

## Java, 21 bytes

```
a->b->(a+b)*(b-a+1)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU49C8IwEN3zKzImSqN1rRZcBAdxKE7icP2S1DQJyVUo0t9eIxYRB99y7@7evXcN3CFqytsoW2sc0ib0okOpRN3pAqXRYq9xN/GE/JWdNLj@aCsHaFxCiO1yJQtaKPCeHkBq@iA0YJp7BAzlbmRJ27BlGTqpr@cLBXf1fBK/8PXC@jcnpfVmhCjNo5TBPOczlkcwj/liNSYfg6z3WLXCdChsyEClWS3AWtWzmL/J1gdnFi85f58NZBif)

Answer (score 2):

## Awk, 24 bytes

`$0=""($1+$2)*($2-$1+1)/2`

Incorporated manatwork's suggestion.

Comment: Is shorter if you make it pattern instead of action: `$0=""($1+$2)*($2-$1+1)/2`.

Answer (score 2):

## Applescript, <s>147</s> 137 Bytes

Welp. I'm not winning.

```
set a to(text returned of(display dialog""default answer""))
set b to(text returned of(display dialog""default answer""))
(b-a+1)*(b+a)/2
```

Since I'd never seen an Applescript answer before, I decided I'd make one, then immediately realized why it never had been done.

The explanation is fairly straightforward -

```
set ... to (text returned of (display dialog "" default answer ""))
            ^
            Get the text of                     ^ the user inputs an answer here

(b-a+1)*(b+a)/2
^ with nothing else below this, Applescript recognizes it as the final
  value and prints to console.
```

Comment: Yes, I recognize that on compile, Applescript "helpfully" spaces everything out - this will still compile and run _as is_, however.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 29 bytes

Based on standard stricks to set variables (eg register_globals oldSkool)

```
while($b>=$a)$r+=$b--;echo$r;
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, 18 Bytes

```
sum(scan():scan())
```

Answer (score 2):

## Groovy, 19 Bytes

```
{a,b->(a..b).sum()}
```

Answer (score 2):

## 05AB1E, 2 bytes

```
ŸO
```

Explanation:

```
      # Implicit input
      # Implicit input
  Ÿ   # Push [a...b]
   O  # Sum list
      # Implicit print
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xbhP&input=MQoz)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 1 byte

```
ṡ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwi4bmhIiwiIiwiNVxuOCJd)
([2 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuaHiiJEiLCIiLCI1XG44Il0=) flagless)

Explanation:

```
ṡ  # Push the range from a to b
   # s flag sums the top of the stack
   # Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 22 bytes

```
->a,b{eval [*a..b]*?+}
```

Just as long as using the expression in @xnor's Python answer:

```
->a,b{(a+b)*(b-a+1)/2}
```

Test it:

```
->a,b{eval [*a..b]*?+}[10,20] #=> 165
```

Comment: Not everyone is posting incomplete snippets. When not otherwise specified, one should assume that answers must use one of our default input methods.

Comment: @AlexA. yup, but I think the challenge is poorly worded. I'll check back later and update if it's been rephrased. Gotta run.

Answer (score 1):

## [Math++](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Math%2B%2B), 23 bytes

```
?>a
?>b
(b-a+1)*(b+a)/2
```

Answer (score 1):

## Squirrel, 21 bytes

```
@(a,b)(b-a+1)*(b+a)/2
```

Creates an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

#### [J](http://jsoftware.com/stable.htm), 19 bytes

```
   f=:4 :'+/x+i.1+y-x'
   1 f 1
1
   1 f 2
3
   5 f 10
45
```

It would be longer if it calculated the answer directly, because it would need some parentheses. I can't quickly find a builtin way to "range from a to b", so it does:

```
                    # The parameters are x on the left, y on the right
f=:4 : '            # f is a dyad verb defined as...

 +/                  # The sum of ...
   x +               # x added to the list of ...  (turns 0 1.. to x x+1..)
       i.            # the integers from 0 to ...  
          1+y-x      # 1 + y -x                    (sequence length)

'                    # end definition string.


5 f 10 ->

1 + 10 - 5 =
6

i. 6 = 
0 1 2 3 4 5     

5 + 0 1 2 3 4 5 =
5 6 7 8 9 10

+/ 5 6 7 8 9 10 =
5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 =
45
```

Comment: Have you tried the algorithms from Dennis' and my APL answers?

Comment: @ThomasKwa Not yet, I can't even follow them. (Your APL answer has one character which my browser can't render and can't copy into the TryAPL site, one that I can't follow the TryAPL cheat sheet explanation, and I don't know what an index origin is. Dennis's answer - sounds like a train might become a J hook or fork, but I haven't tried to follow what it's doing).

Comment: you don't need to count `f=:` so this is really 16 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 39 bytes

As usual not even close to the shortest answer:

```
<?=array_sum(range($argv[1],$argv[2]));
```

Runs from command line like:

```
php sum.php 10 20
```

Comment: Not a wonderfull solution, but +1 for doing the same thing I thought of

Comment: @Martijn Thanks. I couldn't think of anything shorter even using the calculation `($a+$b)*($b-$a+1)/2` isn't shorter than using the long function names.

Comment: I base my php answers on `register_globals` in the old settings, so `$_GET['a']` would be accessable via `$a`, saving bytes

Comment: @Martijn Yeah, but you can't post any answer [that runs in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) or better, right?

Comment: Nope. 'luckily' I've got a 5.2 test environment so I can apply this. Then again, I cant use the funky new possibilities

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 2, 27 bytes

Swift seems to be able to infer types much more easily these days...

`let f={($0+$1)*($1-$0+1)/2}`

Called with `f(a, b)`

Answer (score 1):

### C++11 lambda, 37 bytes

```
[&b](int a,int&b){b=(a+b)*(b-a+1)/2;}
```

Invocation:

```
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    std::cin >> a; std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << ([&b](int a,int&b){b=(a+b)*(b-a+1)/2;}(a,b),b) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need `[&b]`? You're still taking it as a reference in the argument list.

Comment: even if it did, `[&]` is one byte shorter

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 6](http://perl6.org) (14 chars / bytes)

The only obvious solution is to create a list from `a` to `b`, and then to reduce it with the addition operator.

```perl6
[+] a..b
```

That would be a snippet, so let's place it in a pointy block.
( One of the ways to create a lambda expression. )

```perl6
-> \a, \b { [+] a..b } # 22 chars

->\a,\b{[+] a..b} # 17 chars
```

Or better yet use a placeholder parameterized block.

```perl6
{[+] $^a..$^b} # 14 chars
```

Examples of it's use:

```perl6
say {[+] $^a..$^b}(4,7) # 22␤

# store it as a subroutine and in a scalar
my &s = my $s = {[+] $^a..$^b};

say s 4,8; # 30␤
say $s.(3,8); # 33␤

say ( {[+] $^a..$^b} for 4,7, 4,8, 3,8, ); # (22 30 33)␤
```

---

If you wanted to be cheap, you could modify the parser by adding a list summation operator. Which technically could be considered a new language at that point. Although that would be a made up language so wouldn't be a valid answer anyway.
( This is actually how it might be written in the [Rakudo](http://rakudo.org) implementation if it was added )

```perl6
sub prefix:<∑> (+@a) is looser(&[,]) {
  [+] @a
}

### new language starts here ###

{∑$^a..$^b} # only 11 chars / 12 bytes in UTF8
```

( Scoring it with bytes feels wrong because Perl 6 and thus this new anonymous language only deal with graphemes in strings. )

Answer (score 1):

### [Minkolang 0.8](http://www.esolangs.org/wiki/Minkolang), 14 bytes (INVALID)

Minkolang was created after this challenge was posted, so I post this answer only in the sense of contributing to a catalog.

```
nndr-[d1-]$+N.
```

#### Explanation

```
n     input as integer (stack: a)
n     input as integer (stack: a,b)
d     duplicate top of stack (stack: a,b,b)
r     reverses stack (stack: b,b,a)
-     subtraction (stack: b,b-a)
[     starts a For loop that will run b-a times
 d    duplicates top of stack
 1-   subtracts 1
]     closes For loop (stack: b,b-1,b-2,...,a+1,a)
$+    sums the stack
N.    outputs as integer and stops
```

[Try it here.](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=nnd0g-%5Bd1-%5D%24%2BN.)

---

The formula-based solutions like what I used in my Befunge and ><> answers are 2 and 3 bytes longer, respectively:

```
nd1-*nd1+*r-2:N.
ndnd3R-1+1R+*2:N.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jolf](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf), 4 bytes

Try it [here](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=dXNqSg)!

```
usjJ
u    sum of
 s   the inclusive range between
  jJ two inputs
```

Answer (score 1):

## jq, 25 characters

(24 characters code + 1 character command line option)

```
[range(.[0];.[1]+1)]|add
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ jq -s '[range(.[0];.[1]+1)]|add' <<< '10 15'
75
```

### jq, 27 characters

(24 characters code + 3 character penalty)

```
[range(.[0];.[1]+1)]|add
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ jq '[range(.[0];.[1]+1)]|add' <<< '[10,15]'
75
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=[range%28.[0]%3B.[1]%2B1%29]|add&j=[10,15])

Not specifically interesting, just the `-s` option which comes handy here: it interprets raw input as array. (Yes, the code itself is identical in both solutions.)

Answer (score 1):

## [PlatyPar](https://github.com/cyoce/PlatyPar), 2 bytes

```
_s
```

[Try it online](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/ParStack/master/page.html?code=_s)!

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 40 Bytes

Used the same method as the Javascript answer, but in Lua.

```
function y(a,b)return(a+b)*(b-a+1)/2 end
```

You use this as such

```
y(3, 6) --3 + 4 + 5 + 6 == 18
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

**Solution:**

```
+/^/!:'|0 1+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X1s/Tl/RSr3GQMFQ20jB/P9/AA)

**Examples:**

```
> +/^/!:'|0 1+2 7
27
> +/^/!:'|0 1+5 10
45
```

**Explanation:**

Slightly different to doing `.5*(x+y)*1+y-x`. Instead, calculate ranges, take largest except smallest and then sum up:

```
+/^/!:'|0 1+ / solution
        0 1+ / vectorised addition of 0 1 / 2 7 -> 2 8
       |     / reverse:                   / 2 8 -> 8 2
    !:'      / til (!:) each (')          / (8;2) -> (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7;0 1)
  ^/         / except (^) over (/)        / (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7;0 1) -> 2 3 4 5 6 7
+/           / add (+) over (/) aka sum   / 2 3 4 5 6 7 -> 27
```

Comment: I think [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqrpSW78iXrGy9n9atJG1eSxXWrSptaFB7H8A) is possible with `{y+/x_!y}`

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/j-uby), 9 Bytes

```rb
:!~|:/&:+
```

Explanation:

```rb
:!~         generate range a..b
   |        then
    :/&:+   sum it together
```

Expansion:

```rb
:!~|:/&:+
->(a,b){ (:/&:+).(a!~b) }
->(a,b){  :+ / (a !~ b) }
->(a,b){ (a..b).reduce(:+) }
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html), 13 bytes

Even shorter bash solution:

```bash
seq -s+ $@|bc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UEG3WFtBxaEmKfn///9G/80B)

#### Explanation

`seq -s+ $@` called with for example `2 7` prints `2+3+4+5+6+7`, this gets piped to `bc` which evaluates it & prints the result.

Answer (score 1):

## [Symbolic Python](https://github.com/FTcode/Symbolic-Python), 49 bytes (46 + 3 penalty)

```
_=(_[_==_]*-~_[_==_]-_[_>_]*~-_[_>_])/-~(_==_)
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/3lYjPjre1jY@Vku3DsrSBdJ2QIE6KENTX7dOAySj@f///2hDYx0FQ/NYAA)**

Anything involving `range`, `len`, or loops would be too difficult in Symbolic Python, and so I decided the easiest way was to use the formula:

$$ \sum_{r=a}^b r = \frac{b(b+1) - a(a-1)}{2}  $$

Answer (score 1):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 20 bytes

```
OcaxcmszOcaxaclaz2do
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Mzb@/98/ObEiObe4CkQnJuckVhml5P//b6hgbAYA)

### Explanation

This answer uses the following formula to calculate it: $$a + (a+1) + (a+2) + \cdots + b = {a-a^2+b+b^2 \over 2}$$

```
O       O            | Get a and b as two integers delimited by whitespace
 ca                  | (a                  )
   xcm               | (  - a^2            )
      sz      la     | (        + (       ))
         ca          | (          (b      ))
           xac       | (          (  + b^2))
                z2d  | (                   ) / 2
                   o | Print it
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 8 chars, 16 bytes

```
{+/⍺..⍵}
```

test:

```
  f←{+/⍺..⍵}
  1 f 2
3
  2 f 10
54
```

This it is 6 chars but I not find a way to assign a name to it

```
+/↑../
```

Using as function 2 3

Answer (score 1):

### [Reg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg) (a.k.a Unofficial Keg), 17 bytes

Try it online behavior is unknown.

```
¿¿ï_'(:|_)(+).
```

This takes 2 inputs separated by newlines.

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 7 bytes (SBCS is on [Keg wiki](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg/wiki/))

```
¿¿ɧ∑+).
```

Explanation

```
¿¿#      Two nice inputs
  ɧ#     Generate range
   ∑+)#  Summation (looks quite weird because ∑ translates to (!;|. )
      .# Output as integer
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y05N////0P5D@08uf9QxUVtT7/9/Qy5LAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 21 bytes

```
f(a,b)=(a+b)(b-a+1)/2
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dvppbidnqf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 23 bytes

```
/@M\-:2*t.{
\MO/.h*2:~{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/fwTdG18pIq0SvmivG119fL0PLyKqu@v///4b/DQ0A)

### Flattened

```
/MM/.h*2:~.t*2:-\O@
/                      Switch to Ordinal
 MM                    Read the two command line arguments
   /                   Back to cardinal
    .h*2:              (a*a+1)/2, the sum of all the integer between 0 and a
         ~             Swap the stack values
          .t*2:        (b*b-1)/2, the sum of all the integer between 0 and b-1
               -       Diff between the two sums
                \      Switch to Ordinal
                 O     Print the result to the output
                  @    Bye
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 19 bytes

```
O/*+E=aP=bP+1-b a 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKWyNLAdJsFVbNjJFspCilgALye0H8AVZlkF1suyTZFiWcH89193zopFtcpe75YNlzTzd0/1MT3ePiXp3UfTtTZJF6XIS7xflJJm/vR82zZE0GdeGovJpEa@A8iS7qw2VyUxgJvE0yWKWpiydZ3f00dSjn84@f2Re9Xr16ZL51evfDi/ZXvV6fPae/Vy9Xn5mXgU@Pr0ysGefTw3o57OPh1e/WgVnFn602b@8n7iePbyCZcVkdB/mzOaVgIkCW7WK4ZDtVXNnR7/jZAaT5NFXht/391cwuAxh0E3ApClHYA3z7vz8lED4cUBO9tE3w5DLDwIA8oatD2G6jDm/zka82SQ/YFeuR8Fl6@j82Pp2vmN3j4LwIhhfdL3emIXM/8ZhpjUQYBvQcThjAYoNmk3QvQjzIrY4e242kqxkyaDZgFFax2H2dJlFMELCEbyXs4VTLLJrfxQ8u477AjoaCagjPDxdHNjZQfXJgj3eJ2VcLMIobjbgexpbMA7iljDDYa2b8ia7md7k7PnlemTx/psWJ1MayZRZ2tqAdd50OBMq1OgWjN5kMNztihGwsxGnRWwOvAhzovs4@gebznOWLWfjOC@kPcxKiklyl5RKK6yO7niO9kg8bea5rMtsaXm3y1mPddwOLIGWJpzlcbnMM6YiQ4hRcAxWbXgI8yQcp7GyAoxI549xbkWwnjKEff3KlHERvUVExJcOl/QkG1xPAs@BPQr08Ip1eNZkTAIkmywXFm4pk5z2GLytGyxOfiG0CTNuOp3KplZHbBoIgwfaKAZKIFPAd7BsERYlK@9jUBbmJYDlBtiKUdzQiKMnyljjAL1qLHx6nDa6UZFB5mPolsk8A7MxYt0RmBYpRorlYoGEcxVVasSk34w/oN0gG3WoUF5kEMeQtTBypeWClU8dfbTFwDEOYAbrY@ZCM1WQUdITrlpoN5oapuk8svZcx@PoIA5rJ8jBbJmmYf5kOlrtz6WxPRcdbRktKOWX2Yo0LeHhEjIpbPL08Ojd@9vftk5/OTccNtWOk416/XW9WzXFH06uXtFYxjmpDLMJ@@cyVK@o9sFcYnd9CUHAh47m4mQDFyS8VxeuY14oVebLDHdoIDOvXc4LS@VKOgAQ2mUSMZodL6fX/t5I2iE2uk3pQRtQLOBYlVMLoOD/dppOWirvUOVxUMmqAjgUWoGoaWL9Gm6febt1P9F5jMUD1irzZdyCGNTjGJIwPg0hg@BECyOrVZGAfqLvsvgQHV/ezecpzIzrDLzqa@XW9xyyf9wj08zxmpkp2pj9pTZC0JbzNLVMUx3mOlAh/geTszWTsQp/PLw4c7AWi0CD15Nrz3VdCCdwBV7VW5H8GX8pGT4GRowa3iID8Obgh0@fu4GnSjpmOKzq@KBPXzx2AXB8cnpksykkx0FDh7ZcD9NwFC6cNM6oAzC4Ur2R4AzO3WtkrApibcLShgXHSqiXgFq8T1wMoKgkOKnzRjRbrOwAkZSMqhSCNCUjXKZ4TMro3rKBmbVWCjhi8i/COtU57PQZriIAARKKzRhkYd4mp6R62Q7WQpYPqApXCOo5yxxLF7Wd1yP@XIUZNFCU28XCl7BwXXcOGc/ibfePKf5VyAtAglbB0V1cptAxWm3ayzbuEJbISZLxQTK1LNpPbAii@xxtcSBOORfbHLiDjbbCg1MbINY7EuuJzhGzgSRkoOxFkmTurKx8V/kj8HrmfTWDkibFGnMLGIwGiL9gMV/EmWUs7LTyFrUKYFUwE5US4jHw3b2faVw2F5boSKZg@gSdghYOQtbB/g7g0DvQG64BS6vwsmCQdQNqhfDEApJLukEPrUVUowY7YL7Zs1Q0Vp78Bp7Ef0Abh6d9zc@t2q7TxWALM9ka8HQtPGCVtM6LAf@l05d94oZA1plPVqDWGbXFFtYgrorQcLjHq8ZyLR0q0StqDq3tAgXrh2FdGOiE1sdcFzIpb1VQNYHlJQ4zqfa1EiZrlrkDMrdIFs4rFvBgiIsPkib2s0Yda7fpNtXrIXQk2twbarcbyqztt3YB9ljwxpk6arlh/rIs1O7rmBC9njCoqw2iPAn5ElMyhpaxPaKbbtR3W1xNEQ19P1Ox5Is9x/6XDoPYAELhMJ7yQHnp882hGoWlesiu0@tWNHH1HXVx6EYdepYyR0i/emvRaUQ7tup1e4WQXe3OBhZWy/MGHuw1HsS@bmJhtsE1mzCBqYQEoAZZlCGDzg1c8hA06PVInySKSubqRgtGy9rp3/kuMTubidn@rtD2ZqG/E5s1h8TVgcZ808uBpF2wHrCep1kmLFDvwTnreXDGPBPs/yB6H9JjDRsECKV1@2rEVZQT0f7QlVz7nNoVOyD@m6sHgibJFbgjUILFEgPf8cpwH@dxp2DZHHroJC2TjD2GT8Abm8zhTlrGd3EOMot5FmdlEuItAk7ynD3G7D58iAEoFSG8ZLMwW0L4PL3FUfRujIwDFcREsUxL/NGAFtcJT0F6JkYtuUKZKachK@pR3@tI93VDNGy/hnLpfh6mWBufwOtsksYTdluZfau1POM30ZgZi1TODFFZr6feOcEbEmobpr/oPLhPwbpS@DDp1fJiUM@KB8w8/PvmMUDRvvzRrc0E4IDVGkUadJiRDVGHKyRVyfVFHUDsVgDVxuiChnAoMbTmk3mfzeJZtMAwy9jw9uD/dWX4F7gyVK5sbfAlkL5IVw5eZ1@susFknD5gNYCvEb4qoFub7KxetHsq85gKtHntKv2hL5tqw4EpKVOJlv/638jLHGSo0fKDTt9E19rcVWxQZd369A9fZFRvW91kENeo3WZ0KiQMahwFNWkjTaIEIrpdLSZM/h3cE796mY1mzTtm9i5S7KTetSPUkD/w@7sGLR/ElSEwOqyuWYDW70iZvHg4@izs1hraK0H0itLBasnzN5W8Xa77AF9L79Hgf2iI0DB84lZEuvnX7ZDZG/ngIa7a9bBJogZBxL@YpAchuvIkwOqTeBpCkgTPVIeZZDCZTOhHpDAqoUx1tqMO9pw4wtkrt1hUpmsgdIPyh4RZmGTYrLIwv4scUmrb8P2B489VdL/E/@FYLllTv8a9fNttej/9Gw)

Uses the formula `(a+b)*(b-a+1)/2`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 12 bytes

```factor
[ [a,b] Σ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjkJtYkqFXlJiXnloMYZfmZSbnp6QqFBSllpRUFhRl5pUoWHNxmSiY/Y9WiE7USYpVOLdYIfZ/cmJOjoLefwA)

Interesting tidbit: `sum` (and therefore `Σ`) is a generic (polymorphic) word that specializes on `range`s to efficiently calculate arithmetic sums.

Answer (score 1):

### C, <s>32</s> 28 bytes

```
f(a,b){a=a==b?a:a+f(a+1,b);}
```

**Easier to read**

```
int f(a,b){

  // This ends the recursion by returning the current number
  if(a == b) return a; 

  // This recursively returns the sum of the 
  // current low number and the next low number.
  return a + f(a+1,b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C preprocessor, 40 bytes

`#define S(a,b) (((a)+(b))*((b)-(a)+1)/2)`

Comment: This submission doesn't add anything particularly useful, and is similar to multiple submissions already here. What makes your post different? Perhaps adding that would make it a more popular solution.

Comment: Is codegolf useful? C/C++ cannot compete with interpreted languages in that way, so avoiding typenames and return keyword was the deal.

Answer (score 0):

## Bash/GNU, 21 Bytes

```
expr `seq -s" + " $@`
```

called with arguments `a` and `b`

- `seq` generates a sequence from `a` to `b`, separated by " + "
- `expr` evaluates and prints the resulting expression

Answer (score 0):

## gs2, 5 bytes

```
WÉ'Od          57 90 27 4f 64
```

Read two numbers, dump them on the stack, increment the top one, take the range between them, sum it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com), 60 Bytes

```
func main(){s=0;for(x=input();x<=input();x++)s+=x;print(s);}
```

Run online and see expanded [here](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium/index.php?code=4197f0f7323de972f19066ed968dbd25)

Answer (score 0):

### Burlesque - 6 bytes

`per@++` usage:

```
$ echo "10 20" | blsq --stdin "per@++"
165
```

Answer (score 0):

## [DUP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/DUP), 15 bytes

```
[^^+^3ø-1+*2/.]
```

<kbd>[Try it here!](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/dup.html)</kbd>

Anonymous lambda. Usage:

```
1 10[^^+^3ø-1+*2/.]!
```

## Explanation

Uses the formula `(a+b)*(b-a+1)/2`.

Answer (score 0):

### Elixir, 37 bytes

```
fn(a,b)->Enum.reduce(a..b,0,&+/2)end
```

poster child example for reduce, i guess. allows b > a.

Answer (score 0):

### Seriously, 5 bytes

```
,u,xΣ
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LHUseM6j&input=NAoy)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pylons](https://github.com/morganthrapp/Pylons-lang), 3 bytes

`iks`

How it works:

```
i # Take command line input.
k # Push the inclusive range(stack[-2]..stack[-1])
s # Sum the stack.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Forth, 27 bytes

```forth
0
: f 1+ SWAP DO I + LOOP ;
```

The parameters much be pushed smallest first. Run like this:

```forth
1 4 f .
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/BqVh)

Answer (score 0):

## J, 11 bytes

```
-:@<:@-*-@+
```

This is a tacit verb. Example usage:

```
    v =: -:@<:@-*-@+
    5 v 10
45
```

This verb is a fork of three verbs: `-:@<:@-`, `*`, and `-@+`. A fork `x (f g h) y` is equivalent to `(x f y) g (x h y)`. Thus, `x (-:@<:@-*-@+) y` = `(x(-:@<:@-)y) * (x (-@+) y)`. Likewise, the composition of two verbs `x (f @ g) y` equals `f (x g y)`. Using this rule, given that `<:` decrements, and `-:` divides its argument by two, `x(-:@<:@-)y = (x - y - 1)/2` and `x(-@+)y = -(x+y)`. Therefore `x(-:@<:@-*-@+)y = (x - y - 1) / 2 * -(x+y)`, and by moving the sign from `-(x+y)` to `(x-y-1)`, we get `(y - x + 1) / 2 * (x + y)`.

Comment: Dennis's APL solution translated into J for 7 bytes: `+%2%1--`

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/showcase-your-language-one-vote-at-a-time/86385#86385), 15 bytes

```
::[a,b|d=d+c]?d
```

`::` takes two command line parameters and names them `a` and `b`. Then, we create a `FOR` loop (using iterator `c`) from `a` to `b`. We keep adding `c` to `d`, then print `d` and exit.

Comment: What is QBIC?  Where can I find out about it?  A google search brings up this answer.

Comment: @WheatWizard [This is basically](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/showcase-your-language-one-vote-at-a-time/86385#86385) the most complete repository on what QBIC is and where to get it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Detour](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/detour/master/interp.html), 11 bytes

```
{+(}-!>)*d.
```

This uses the `(a+b)*(b-a+1)/2` formula.

`+` encodes `(a+b)`, `-!>` encodes `(b-a+1)` (really `-(a-b)+1`), and `*d.` multiplies (`*`) the two together, halves it (`d`), and outputs it (`.`). `{…}` makes two copies of a and b and `(…)` manipulate where the two copies go so that the result of `(a+b)` doesn't get fed into the `(b-a+1)` section.

[Try it online!](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/detour/master/interp.html?hex=eysofS0hPikqZC4%3D)

Answer (score 0):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 17 bytes

```
a=>b=>sum(a..b+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@z/R1i7J1q64NFcjUU8vSdtQ839BUWZeiUaahrGmhqmm5n8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 4 bytes

Input order is irrelevant.

```
òV x
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=8lYgeA==&input=OCw4OA==)

Comment: In 2023, this is 2 bytes `òV` `-x`

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 14 bytes

```
Input :.5(YY+Y+X-XX
```

Bonus: no lists or list commands.

Comment: The X-value should be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 19 bytes

18 bytes of code + 1 for `-p`

```perl
map$\+=$_,$_..<>}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUAlRttWJV5HJV5Pz8autvr/f2Mus3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6xYAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 20 bytes

```
=(B1^2+B1-A1^2+A1)/2
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
Σ…
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9ziRw3L/v//b2hg@N/Q0sIEAA)

#### Explanation

```
    -- implicit inputs: A B   |  2 7
 …  -- inclusive range [A,B]  | [2,3,4,5,6,7]
Σ   -- sum                    |  2+3+4+5+6+7  == 27
```

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 2 bytes

```
R+
```

Boring solution, Range from a to b, then sum.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/z9I@////8b/LQA)

Answer (score 0):

## Casio Basic, 20 bytes

```
sum(seq(x,x,a,b))
```

Simple function. 17 bytes for the program, 3 bytes to enter `a,b` as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

## [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.org/), 184 bytes

```
HAI 1.3
I HAS A B
I HAS A J
GIMMEH J
I HAS A Q
GIMMEH Q
MAEK Q A NUMBR
IM IN YR L UPPIN YR i TIL BOTH SAEM DIFF OF Q AN SUM OF i AN J AN -1
	VISIBLE SUM OF i AN J
IM OUTTA YR L
KTHXBYE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxNCsIwFITXvlPMBRRK8QAJpua1ef1LInatLgqF3n8VG6WCm@HjG2aWdXmsz1dKVjGKU0kMqzwU9I9qurKIsRvsatjVQKJMg2FzbRQ9Egu4xTTCIfb9F2cEdtBdsPDKCC5cVeiqvGrho2SeM9c5jgUdbuxZO/Nf5u8uhqA@99QEe9eTSamk4vwG)

Comment: In some interpreters, you can exclude the "HAI" and "KTHXBYE"

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 28 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:sum(range(x,y+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFCp9KquDRXoygxLz1VA8jTNtTU/F9QlJlXopGmkZlXUFqioakDpYEyZuZclgYA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-x`, 3 bytes

```
Nrò
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/36/o8Kb//410zLm4dCsA)

## Explanation

I use `N` to avoid the `+3` input penalty.

I would normally format the input as \$[a,b]\$ and my code would be `rò`.

`N` reads the entire input.

`r` reduces that by: `ò`, which creates the range from \$a\$ to \$b\$.

`-x` sums the output.

Answer (score 0):

## [Alchemist](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Alchemist), 135 bytes

```bash
_+a->
0_+0m+a+b->u+x+v+y
0m+0a+b->v+y
0a+0b+0m+u+v->m
0a+0b+0m+0u+v->m
m+u+v->a+b+m
m+0u+v->b+m
m+0u+0v->
0a+0b+x+y->
0a+0b+0x+y->Out_I
```

Output in unary, [try it online](https://tio.run/##RY2xCoAwDER3f@UonKtDdyc/oaQiKNjJtujXx7aKLuHeS47IPq9L2I6o6iDGdnRggMAbm3Ai4@oKs4kGAvp6kpCNDT/zFe@mFFDh0V9mrj9a58T1ZTaYUnSjqsrQU30ZvAE) or view the remaining \$\texttt{y}\$-atoms [here!](https://tio.run/##RY2xDoMwDER3vsJSRzeSuzKwM/UTkFPSgkSgEk5Evt5NUtQu1t2zz8fLY3J@3kV1QDZdQwOSR0ZruoAHRkxN9lRBNYxky0nAaDr/93SCc5MDWMwX/zTF0lEzB6asL9CvuzgeYXvCFuQdROb1BTI5SIZl8/sVFsfRFeTBuhbOzvrgHmToVZXbG6nNg9SMHw)

### Explanation

Pretty similar to [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177088/48198), uses that \$a \leq b\$: Basically we ensure with `0_` on the second rule that the first rule must always be applied first (initially the universe always contains one 
\$\texttt{_}\$-atom), removing one \$\texttt{a}\$-atom and then summing both \$\texttt{#x} = [1\dotsc \texttt{#a}]\$ and \$\texttt{#y} = [1\dotsc \texttt{#b}]\$ in parallel, once there are no \$\texttt{a}\$- or \$\texttt{b}\$-atoms left, we subtract them and finally print the remaining \$\texttt{y}\$-atoms.

### Ungolfed

```bash
# Remove one a-atom:
_+a->
# Sum [1..#a] (to out_a) and [1..#b] (to out_b) in parallel:
0_+0mov+ a+b->u+out_a+v+out_b
0mov+0a+b->v+out_b
0a+0b+0mov+ u+v->mov
0a+0b+0mov+0u+v->mov
mov + u+ v->a+b+mov
mov +0u+ v->b+mov
mov +0u+0v->
# If we're done with that:
0a+0b+ out_a+out_b->         # difference: out_b - out_b
0a+0b+0out_a+out_b->Out_I    # output rest in unary
```

Comment: invalid now, arg format appears to be different now

Comment: [106](https://tio.run/##Hcq9CsMwEAPg/V5FGLwUOmXv1Ecw/ik00PMZ4g7Jw/eqZJE@kPKnvl@6btM9heXRUwajQHGIooRFUdHISHfpqCwUIlImhny@DLscsOv1/M7UOMRrGTKws84fGWl1v8n9Z2Ou1jcP7Q8)

Comment: [104](https://tio.run/##HYo7CsMwEET7vcogUBNw5T5VjiD0CViQXQWkFPLhvVm5mXnDvPjJx5trH6rB7U8JERYJjJMYye2MjGLojYUE2QrJwGfEJQgmnbj3cl6/Ecq677NRw7RaqqE3ZtUHbVf7jtqkqyt/)

Comment: [102](https://tio.run/##JYq9CoQwEIT7vMoQSCNcZW/lI4T8CCe4q2As4sPfuus1M/MxX9rKd6H1bCLRjxPHBI0Mwu0I3Y@EhKwzdGSjgvqnoMiOUbTUYIRiqlF3N142Z75arHa/J4kM7vPbj7bufIqvDw)

Comment: [101](https://tio.run/##JYq9CoAwEIP3vko46CI4dXfyEUp/BAXPCq1DfXjPVpckXxK3h3XhLRcRS2Y6rEMTD8atGJUMw8G3qCt8p4D4k26odCvI@O469CeZqm782B/zVWz85m9kkUGNTzrLlo4sFF8)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 21 bytes

Input is taken in currying syntax: `f(a)(b)`

```javascript
a=>b=>b*b-a*a-(a+b)*2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i4JiLSSdBO1EnU1ErWTNLWM/ifn5xXn56Tq5eSna6RpmGpqGBpoav4HAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╖c╟Y
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b763c759&i=10+20&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 13 bytes

```
Fia\,q{Yy+i}y
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhZr3TITY3QKqyMrtTNrKyFiUKnF0YaxiwwNIBwA)

Can't find a "sum" operator in Pip's documentation.

##### Explanation

```python
Fia\,q{Yy+i}y  # Implicit input. A on the command line, B on STDIN.
  a\,q         # Inclusive range, A to B
Fi    {    }   # Loop through, with variable i:
        y+i    #  Add i to y (implicitly defaults to 0)
       Y       #  And store the result in y
            y  # After the loop, push y
               # Implicit output.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 3 bytes

```
⇹ŘƩ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//UfvOozOOrfz/34jLAgA)

```
⇹        implicit inputs; swap order
 Ř       Řangify
  Ʃ      Ʃum; implicit print
```

If the input can be taken in the opposite order (B, then A), then a two-byte solution works:

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 2 bytes

```
ŘƩ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6IxjK///t@AyAgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 1 byte

```
I
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuhYLPZcUJyUXQ3kLlhhyGRpA2AA)

Built-in for `I`nclusive range. The flag `S`ums the resulting list.

Answer (score 0):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 54 bytes

```
s/>$/!>/
:a
s/<(!*)><((\1)!+)>/\1<\1!><\2>/
ta
s/<.*//
```

Each number is inputed as unary exclamation marks surrounded by `<>` signs.
Output is just exclamation marks.
For example: `<!><!!!>` gives `!!!!!!`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1jfTkVf0U6fyyqRq1jfRkNRS9PORkMjxlBTUVvTTj/G0CbGUNHOJsYIqKQErERPS1///38boKAiENj9yy8oyczPK/6v6woA)

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 8 bytes

```ruby
:!~|:sum
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWK6wU62qsiktzodwCBbdoYx2zWAh3wQIIDQA)