# The handshake problem

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, combinatorics

The handshake problem is the classic problem that for n people in a room, if they all shake hands, what's the total number of handshakes that occur.

You code should take an input of any number and output the number of handshakes, both in base ten.

Also the code should not let non-integers through. You should output a falsey in this case. The only expected inputs are positive whole integers and positive real numbers - you don't need to worry about complex numbers or strings as inputs. 
This should mean that you should expect `n >= 0`

Test cases

```
(N:handshakes)
0:0
10:45
20:190
10.5:0
1337:893116
```

Normal golfing rules apply and shortest code wins. 
If your code isn't self explanatory, please explain.

Jelly and 05AB1E are the winners, both at 2 bytes

Comment: What exactly can we expect in terms of "non-integer" inputs? (having said that, I feel like the error checking might amount to more than the actual challenge)

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/60106/8478)

Comment: @Sp3000 I have edited the question now. You'll only expect real and whole numbers

Comment: What about negative numbers?

Comment: @MartinEnder indeed it is, but the differ eve is that the handshake problem is slightly more real world

Comment: Might ask for some specifics if that's okay - which of the following might we expect as input?: `-0`, `-1`, `10.`, `10.0`, `.1`, `-.1`, `-10.`, `-10.0`

Comment: Please have a look at our list of [things to avoid when writing challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8047/49110). Bonuses are one of them. I would suggest removing it since it doesn't really add anything to the challenge. Oh, and also check out our [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/49110). That's the place to get rid of some quirks in your challenge before you post it.

Comment: @Sp3000 expect all the positive values

Comment: So... does that mean `-0`, `10.`, `10.0` and `.1`? (I'm assuming you mean nonnegative - sorry for being a pendant, but stuff like this does tend to matter for esoteric languages which don't have an easy number eval function :P)

Comment: If normal golfing rules apply, is there any reason you're [excluding full programs](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/42963)?

Comment: @Sp3000 no thank you for asking. This is my first question so it's good to know how accurate I need to be in question defining. I wouldn't count -0 as some language would need to evaluate this first. So all numbers greater than 0.

Comment: Is erroring on invalid inputs allowed?

Comment: @TimmyD sorry didn't actually realise that was a set rule

Comment: @george Er... that's fine, welcome! Bit confused now though, since you said "greater than 0" in the comments but wrote "expect n>=0"

Comment: @LeakyNun if you mean that it will give an error when an invalid n in entered no.

Comment: @Sp3000 whoops, yes greater than or equal to is correct. As in the test case 0

Comment: I'm having a think about this challenge and was wondering - why does the challenge allow floats as input, out of curiosity? I'm not sure the error checking adds much to the challenge (and it also makes the challenge a lot harder and less nice for some languages)

Comment: Also, *Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf!* I recommend posting future challenges to the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) where they can get meaningful feedback before being posted to the main site. Enjoy your stay!

Comment: @TimmyD thanks! I will do in future

Comment: @Sp3000 when I coded the question myself, it was just n*(n-1)/2 which could take any value, but in the context of the question, there will only be a whole positive number of people in the room, so although it is computable for a float number, it is not contextual

Comment: "*I've searched for this question and couldn't find it*" is often a strong hint that the question is really boring.

Comment: @PeterTaylor so the game is over? No more new questions except for boring ones?

Comment: @edc65, the subtext that you read should not be "Don't search to see whether your question is a dupe" but "If you think it necessary to justify posting the question, think twice about posting it. Then if you're still planning to post it, think a third time."

Comment: @PeterTaylor Aren't you suppose to check that a question has not been asked before? If one does not and it is a dupe, it was a waste of a post. Correct me if I'm wrong but that's is how I thought is worked here?

Comment: @george Yes, you should search for dupes. But if you have to start by *explaining* that you did, it's a good indicator that it's either 1) very trivial, or 2) so close to being a dupe you needed to justify it. Neither are promising.

Comment: @Geobits okay that's interesting. I'll keep it in mind

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan sorry I should have removed that after TimmyD's comment. It can be a full program, or just a function, unnamed or names. In PPCG any style of answer is accepted

Comment: This would be *massively* better if [invalid input did not need to be considered](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8858/45941). [Arbitrarily overriding the defaults](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8065/45941) is a bad idea.

Comment: @Mego see my previous reply about the context of the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Jelly, 2 bytes

```
c2
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=YzI&input=&args=MTMzNw)

Comment: Note to others: Due to a bug in Jelly's source, this errored (and, therefore, produced the correct, empty output for non-integer arguments. This has been fixed, but the answer is valid in the penultimate revision of the Jelly interpreter.

Comment: Is an empty output falsey?

Comment: @DrGreen The empty string is falsy in Jelly, so I'd say it is.

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript ES6, 16

```js
n=>n%1?0:~-n*n/2
```

*Test*

```js
f=n=>n%1?0:~-n*n/2

function test()
{
  var i=I.value
  O.textContent=f(i)
}
```

```html
<input id=I oninput=test()><span id=O></span>
```

Comment: One of the shortest JavaScript answers I've seen :-)

Comment: What's the advantage of this over n=>(n-1)*n/2?

Comment: @Eterm the advantage of `~-n` over `(n-1)` is 2 bytes less. The test of `n%1` is required from the spec to detect non-integer input

Comment: Thanks edc, this is why I'm a terrible golfer, I always miss half the requirements.

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

Code:

```
2c
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MmM&input=MTMzNw).

Comment: Oh, so 05AB1E programs are just Jelly programs backwards?

Comment: So *that's* how they're so short!

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
2Xn
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Mlhu&input=MTMzNw)

The code computes the binomial coefficient "*n* choose 2", where *n* is the input. For non-integer input no output is produced.

```
       % Take input implicitly
2      % Push 2
Xn     % n-choose-k
       % Display implicitly
```

Comment: This is a good way to crack it, I though that it was possible, but doubted any languages had a built in combination func

Comment: @george I think that's what the Jelly and 05AB1E answers do too

Comment: @Luis_Mendo Ah probably because they use c for combination rather than p which is permutation

Answer (score 6):

## Brainfuck, <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
,[-[->+>+<<]>[-<+>]<]
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/C1rZ/2) Note, that brainfuck takes input and output through ASCII, so to enter a "49", you enter ascii value 49, e.g. `1`. Brainfuck has no concept of non-integers, so it is impossible to enter one.

Answer (score 5):

### Matlab, <strike>61</strike> 23 bytes

```
@(x)~mod(x,1)*x*(x-1)/2
```

Improvements courtesy [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo).

*Old answer:*

<strike>`@(x)eval('if isnumeric(x) disp((mod(x,1)==0)*x*(x-1)/2);end')`</strike>

An anonymous function that calls `eval`. Matlab considers all numbers entered to be doubles unless you explicitly tell it otherwise, so testing for integerness via built-in isn't really an option unless you want to condition your input heavily-- thus the isnumeric and the mod1.

As well, Matlab doesn't allow conditional statements in anonymous functions, so you have to kludge around that by way of an `eval` statement that evaluates a string. So fun.

The "falsey" output is that it doesn't print anything at all for nonnumerics and prints `0` for a non-integer numeric. For a valid input, it will print the result.

Comment: Why do you need `isnumeric`? The input is guaranteed to be numeric. Also, you can use `~` instead of `==0`. And `disp` is not needed, because [function output is allowed by defaut](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2456/36398). So you could just use `@(x)~mod(x,1)*x*(x-1)/2`

Comment: Matlab errors on a non-numeric input to mod(), so I was coding to prevent that; I didn't realize that we'd only be expected to ever receive numeric inputs! Also I didn't realize I didn't have to disp(). Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! And very good answer BTW. We need more Matlab answers here! :-)

Answer (score 4):

**Python, <strike>37</strike> <strike>50</strike>, <strike>46</strike>, <strike>32</strike>, 26  bytes**

```
lambda a:a%1==0and a*~-a/2
```

Making use of the fact that the solution of the handshake problem is (N-1) + (N-2) ... 2 + 1 for N people. The most problematic is the falsey value when a non-int is given.

Big thanks to Leaky Nun and Martin Ender!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, and have fun here!

Comment: @LeakyNun Thanks a lot for the improvements and the welcome!

Comment: What does ~ mean. Is that Python 2 only?

Comment: @george `~` is bitwise not, equivalent to `-n-1`. It's also in Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 7 bytes

```
ri_(*2/
```

Computes *n**(*n*−1), where *n* is the input. For non-integer input it produces no output.

[**Try it online!**](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cmlfKCoyLw&input=MTMzNw)

```
r     e# Read input
i     e# Convert to integer
_     e# Duplicate
(     e# Subtract 1
*     e# Multiply
2/    e# Divide by 2.
      e# Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, 19 bytes

```
#(#-1)/2/._Real->0&
```

This first computes the result using the explicit formula `n(n-1)/2` but then replaces it with `0` if the that gives a floating-point result.

Just for fun, some alternatives to computing the result (minus the input validation) are:

```
#~Binomial~2
Tr@Range@#-#
n~Sum~{n,#-1}
PolygonalNumber@#-#
```

Answer (score 3):

### R, 28 bytes

Returns `0` if the input, `x`, is not an integer

```
x=scan();(x%%1==0)*x*(x-1)/2
```

Answer (score 3):

### [ArnoldC](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ArnoldC), 266 bytes

ArnoldC has no concept of non-integers, so it is impossible to enter one.

```
LISTEN TO ME VERY CAREFULLY f
I NEED YOUR CLOTHES YOUR BOOTS AND YOUR MOTORCYCLE n
GIVE THESE PEOPLE AIR
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE r
YOU SET US UP 0
GET TO THE CHOPPER r
HERE IS MY INVITATION n
GET DOWN 1
YOU'RE FIRED n
HE HAD TO SPLIT 2
ENOUGH TALK
I'LL BE BACK r
HASTA LA VISTA, BABY
```

Explanations:

```
DeclareMethod f
        MethodArguments n
        NonVoidMethod
        DeclareInt r
        SetInitialValue 0
            AssignVariable r
                   SetValue n
                   MinusOperator 1
                   MultiplicationOperator n
                   DivisionOperator 2
            EndAssignVariable
        Return r
EndMethodDeclaration
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
?sIQ.cQ2Z
.x.cQ2Z
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.x.cQ2Z&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A10%0A20%0A10.5%0A1337&debug=0)

Comment: Erroring with nothing on stdout is considered falsy.

Comment: @isaacg You know, the OP said ["if you mean that it will give an error when an invalid n in entered no."](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82895/the-handshake-problem/82898?noredirect=1#comment202057_82895)

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, 5 bytes

```
ri,1b
```

Prints nothing (except to STDERR) for non-integer input.

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cmksMWI&input=MTMzNw)

#### Explanation

```
ri  e# Read input and try to convert to integer N.
,   e# Turn into range [0 1 2 ... n-1].
1b  e# Sum the list by treating it as base-1 digits. We do this instead of
    e# a simple reduction (:+) because the latter fails for empty lists.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Desmos, 11 bytes

```
.5nn-.5n
n=1
```

[Try it here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ll7dztszzp)

Ungolfed formula:
[image: (n(n-1))/2]

Comment: This does not seem to handle the non-integers case.

Comment: @ Mama Fun Roll Do you expect for there to be partial people there?

Comment: It is a test case that you have to handle. "Also the code should not let non-integers through. You should output a falsey in this case."

Comment: That's why I have the variable slider set to integers.

Comment: Oh, I was entering input through the text box. Nevermind, sorry :P

Comment: Yeah, you can always increase the upper limit

Answer (score 2):

### [Hoon](https://github.com/urbit/urbit), 30 bytes

```
|=
n/@
(div (mul n (dec n)) 2)
```

Just compute `(n * (n-1))/2`.
Hoon is strongly typed, so you *can't* call this function with a float or negative number.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 22 bytes

```
lambda z:sum(range(z))
```

Makes use of Python's standard library. Raises an error whenever the function is fed with a non-integer.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first post!

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, <strike>32</strike> 16 bytes

```
lambda n:n*~-n/2
```

Throws an error if n is not an integer.

Old Version:

```
lambda n:(0,n*~-n/2)[n==int(n)]
```

Comment: Uou can use bitwise operators ~- to remove the brackets. Do n*~-n/2

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Unfortunately, the spec requires the output to be falsy if the input is non-integral.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v2+, 33 bytes

```
param($n)$n*($n-1)/2*($n-is[int])
```

Full program. 20 bytes to compute `n(n-1)/2` and 13 bytes to validate input. Uses the [`-is` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847763.aspx), so requires V2 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

## J, <s>14</s> 8 bytes

```
2&!*]=<.
```

6 bytes saved thanks to [miles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6710/miles)!

Explaination:

```
2&!      NB. Binomial coefficient of 2 and the argument
   *     NB. Times...
    ]=<. NB. argument == floor(argument)
```

Previous solution: `-:@(*<:)*(=<.)`

Comment: You can use `!` to calculate the binomial coefficient. Then you can shorten it to `2&!*]=<.` for 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 9 bytes

```
2∘!×(|=⌊)
```

The chose-2 times (whether the abs equals the floor).

Answer (score 1):

## dc, 18 bytes

```
[d/]sqdX0!=qd1-*2/
```

#### Explanation

```
[d/]sq
```

Store in register `q` a macro that replaces top of stack with 1 (by dividing by itself).

```
dX0!=q
```

If there are any fraction digits, then execute the macro.

```
d1-*2/
```

Compute ½n(n-1).  If we started with 1 (either as input or because a non-integer value was entered) the result will be 0.

Answer (score 1):

## Factor with `load-all`, 12 bytes

```
[ iota sum ]
```

Same as [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82978/46231).

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 363 bytes

I thought I ought to make sure everybody gets a chance to meet everybody else.

Unfortunately some of the party guests do have to ask if they've met someone before, to avoid shaking someone's hand twice. Hopefully the guests are pretty good at recognizing faces.

Golfed:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;public class H{static int h = 0;public static void main(String[] a){int b = Integer.parseInt(a[0]);P[] e = new P[b];for(int i=0;i<b;i++){e[i] = new P();}for(P p : e){for(P o : e){p.s(o);}}System.out.print(h);}}class P {ArrayList<P> l = new ArrayList<P>();void s(P o){if(o.equals(this)){return;}if(!o.l.contains(this)){H.h++;l.add(o);}}}
```

Un-golfed:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PartyHost {
    static int shakes = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int amount = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        Person[] people = new Person[amount];
        for(int i=0; i<amount;i++){
            people[i] = new Person();
            // welcome to the party!
        }
        // well, we gotta get this party rockin'. hey, have you met my friend...
        for(Person p : people){
            for(Person other : people){
                p.handshake(other);
            }
        }
        System.out.print(shakes);
    }
}

class Person {
    ArrayList<Person> already_shook = new ArrayList<Person>();
    void handshake(Person other){
        // hmm, have we met already?
        if(other.equals(this)){
            // I mean, I guess I could shake hands with myself... maybe later.
            return;
        }
        if(!other.already_shook.contains(this)){
            // it seems not!
            // *firm grasp. maintain eye contact*
            // uh oh don't hold on too long
            // hope he doesn't grab too early or too late
            PartyHost.shakes++;
            already_shook.add(other);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 25 bytes

A subroutine:

```
{($_=pop)*!/\D/*($_-1)/2}
```

See it in action:

```
perl -e'print sub{($_=pop)*!/\D/*($_-1)/2}->(3.14)'
```

Comment: `\.` would work as well as `\D`.

Answer (score 0):

## , 5 chars / 7 bytes

```
МƦ⁽ï2
```

<kbd>[Try it here (ES6 browsers only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=true&input=10&code=%D0%9C%C6%A6%E2%81%BD%C3%AF2)</kbd>

Builtins are pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

## [RETURN](https://github.com/molarmanful/RETURN), 8 bytes

```
[$1-×2÷]
```

<kbd>[Try it here.](http://molarmanful.github.io/RETURN/)</kbd>

Anonymous lambda that leaves result as top of stack. Usage:

```
10[$1-×2÷]!
```

## Explanation

```
[      ]  lambda
 $1-      n-1
    ×     *n
     2÷   /2
```

Answer (score 0):

## Google Sheets, <s>17</s> 14 bytes

```
=((B1^2)-B1)/2
```

Cell B1 is the input.

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 15 bytes

```
f x=sum[1..x-1]
```

`[x..y]` ranges are inclusive...

Oh and I don't know how to handle the non-integers...

Answer (score 0):

### [Golisp](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/golisp), 18 bytes

```
{(n)~[+range[1n]]}
```

Python equivalent: `lambda n: sum(range(1, n))`.

Oh and Golisp don't have floating point number (for now)