# Subtract the next numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic

## Description

Subtract the next P numbers from a N number. The next number of N is N + 1.

Look at the examples to get what I mean.

## Examples:

```
Input: N=2,P=3
Calculate: n - (n+1) - (n+2) - (n+3)     //Ending with 3, because P=3
Calculate: 2 -  2+1  -  2+2  - 2+3       //Replacing N with 2 from Input
Calculate: 2 -  3    -  4    - 5
Output: -10


Input: N=100,P=5
Calculate: n - (n+1) - (n+2) - (n+3) - (n+4) - (n+5)
Calculate: 100-  101 -  102  -  103  -  104  - 105
Output: -415


Input: N=42,P=0
Calculate: n
Calculate: 42
Output: 42


Input: N=0,P=3
Calculate: n - (n+1) - (n+2) - (n+3)
Calculate: 0 -  1    -  2    -  3
Output: -6


Input: N=0,P=0
Calulate: n
Calculate: 0
Output: 0
```

## Input:

**N**: Integer, positive, negative or 0

**P**: Integer, positive or 0, not negative

## Output:

Integer or String, leading 0 allowed, trailing newline allowed

## Rules:

- No loopholes
- This is code-golf, so shortest code in bytes wins
- Input and Output must be as described

Comment: The essential challenge here is calculating triangle numbers.

Comment: There's more to this than just triangular numbers; the start point is arbitrary as well as the number of subtractions, which may be zero.

Comment: Also, for triangular numbers it's possible that doing the actual sum is shorter than using the closed form, whereas you can't just compute arbitrary polygonal numbers by summing a range from 0 to N. (I'd agree with the close vote if the other challenge just asked for triangular numbers.)

Comment: for the `Input: N=0,P=3` example, your expansion has some extraneous double-negatives

Comment: @JDL, the part which is "more than just triangle numbers" is a simple multiplication: `N * (P-1)`. That's virtually the *definition* of *trivial*.

Comment: why are there double minuses for N=0,P=3? Typo, right?

Comment: @MartinEnder, someone on meta found [an even closer duplicate](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/60106/194).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>5</s> 3 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan)

```
Ý+Æ
```

**Explanation**

Takes P then N as input.

```
       # implicit input, ex 5, 100
Ý      # range(0,X): [0,1,2,3,4,5]
 +     # add: [100,101,102,103,104,105]
  Æ    # reduced subtraction: 100-101-102-103-104-105
```

Comment: Ahhh, I almost wanted to post my solution haha. Also, for three bytes: `Ý+Æ` :).

Comment: It only switches the input (`P` goes first)

Comment: @Adnan: I didn't even know 05AB1E had `Ý`... I thought only 1-based range existed.

Comment: In which character encoding is that only 3 Bytes? ;-)

Comment: @yankee: CP-1252

Answer (score 17):

## Python 2, <s>26 24</s> 23 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @Adnan (replace `p*(p+1)/2` with `p*-~p/2`)
-1 byte thanks to @MartinEnder (replace `-p*-~p/2` with `+p*~p/2`

```python
lambda n,p:n-p*n+p*~p/2
```

Tests are on [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/gRzpwa)

Answer (score 11):

### CJam, 8 bytes

```
{),f+:-}
```

[Test suite.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=2%203%0A100%205%0A42%200%0A0%203%0A0%200%5D2%2F%7B~%0A%0A%7B)%2Cf%2B%3A-%7D%0A%0A~p%7D%2F)

Too bad that the closed form solution is longer. :|

#### Explanation

```
),  e# Get range [0 1 ... P].
f+  e# Add N to each value to get [N N+1 ... N+P].
:-  e# Fold subtraction over the list, computing N - (N+1) - (N+2) - ... - (N+P).
```

Answer (score 11):

### Haskell, 21 bytes

```
a#b=foldl1(-)[a..a+b]
```

Answer (score 10):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
n=>p=>n+p*(~p/2-n)
```

*Saved 1 byte by currying, as suggested by Zwei*
*Saved 1 byte thanks to user81655*

#### Test

```js
let f =
n=>p=>n+p*(~p/2-n)

console.log(f(2)(3))
console.log(f(100)(5))
console.log(f(42)(0))
console.log(f(0)(3))
console.log(f(0)(0))
```

Comment: You can save a byte by currying the function. `n=>p=>...` and calling the function with `f(n)(p)`

Comment: `(n,p)=>n-p*(++p/2+n)` will also works in C#.

Comment: `n-p*(++p/2+n)` is equivalent to `n+p*(~p/2-n)`.

Answer (score 8):

## Haskell, <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
n#p=n+sum[-n-p..n]
```

Previous 19 bytes solutions

```
n#p=n-n*p-(p*p+p)/2
n#p=n-sum[n+1..n+p]
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
r+_/
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=citfLw&input=&args=MTAw+NQ)

#### How it works

```
r+_/  Main link. Arguments: n, p

 +    Yield n+p.
r     Range; yield [n, ..., n+p].
  _/  Reduce by subtraction.
```

Answer (score 7):

## C#, <strike>21</strike> 20 bytes

*Edit: Saved one byte thanks to [TheLethalCoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38550/thelethalcoder)*

```
N=>P=>N-P++*(N+P/2);
```

**[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/IA7KSq)**

Full source, including test cases:

```
using System;

namespace substract
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<int,Func<int,int>>s=N=>P=>N-P++*(N+P/2);
            Console.WriteLine(s(2)(3));     //-10
            Console.WriteLine(s(100)(5));   //-415
            Console.WriteLine(s(42)(0));    //42
            Console.WriteLine(s(0)(3));     //-6
            Console.WriteLine(s(0)(0));     //0

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use currying `N=>P=>` instead of `(N,P)=>` to save 1 byte

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, <s>23</s> 22 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Give n and p (in that order) on separate lines of STDIN:

```
subtract.pl
2
3
^D
```

`subtract.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_-=eval"+2+\$_++"x<>
```

(using `''` quotes to save the `\` invokes a 2 byte penalty because it can't be combined with `-e`)

Same idea and length:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_+=eval"-1-++\$_"x<>
```

Surprisingly doing the actual calculation is shorter than using the direct formula (these `$`'s really hurt for arithmetic)

Answer (score 5):

### C++, <s>54</s> 51 bytes

```
  [](int N,int P){int F=N;while(P--)F-=++N;return F;}
```

<s>[](int N,int P){int F;for(F=N;P;F-=++N,P--);return F;}</s>

### Test:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void)
{
    int N, P;
    std::cin >> N >> P;
    auto f = [](int N,int P){int F=N;while(P--)F-=++N;return F;};
    std::cout << f(N,P) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Unfortunately, [all submissions need to be programs or callable functions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422), whereas this is just a snippet that assumes the input to be stored in pre-defined variables and stores the output in another.

Comment: @MartinEnder I have changed to C++ with  lambda. Is it acceptable?

Comment: Yes, [lambdas are fine](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/should-function-literals-be-allowed-when-a-function-is-asked-for/1503#1503). :)

Comment: You can do this in C with 40 bytes `f;g(n,p){f=n;while(p--)f-=++n;return f;}` using your algorithm

Comment: @cleblanc Thanks for tip - global variable and declaration without an explicit type are really useful. What a pity that C99 standard removed implicit `int`

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 15 bytes

```
#2-##-#(#+1)/2&
```

An unnamed function that receives `P` and `n` as its parameters in that order.

Uses the closed form solution `n - n*p - p(p+1)/2`.

Answer (score 4):

### Pyke, 6 bytes

```
m+mhs-
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=m%2Bmhs-&input=100%0A5&warnings=0)

```
m+     -    map(range(input_2), +input_1)
  mh   -   map(^, +1)
    s  -  sum(^)
     - - input_1 - ^
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
hHyL,?+y:Lx+$_:H+
```

#### Explanation

```
hH                  Input = [H, whatever]
 HyL,               L = [0, …, H]
     ?+             Sum the two elements in the Input
       y            Yield the range from 0 to the result of the sum
        :Lx         Remove all elements of L from that range
           +        Sum the remaining elements
            $_      Negate the result
              :H+   Add H
```

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
:y+s-
```

Inputs are `P` and then `N`.

[Try it at MATL Online!](https://matl.io/?code=%3Ay%2Bs-&inputs=5%0A100&version=19.1.0)

#### Explanation

```
:     % Take P implicitly. Range [1 2 ... P]
      %     Stack: [1 2 ... P]
y     % Take N implicitly at the bottom of the stack, and push another copy
      %     Stack: N, [1 2 ... P], N
+     % Add the top two arrays in the stack , element-wise
      %     Stack: N, [N+1 N+2 ... N+P]
s     % Sum of array
      %     Stack: N, N+1+N+2+...+N+P
-     % Subtract the top two numbers
      %     Stack: N-(N+1+N+2+...+N+P)
      % Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 4):

## Forth, 36 bytes

Simple computation of `n - (p*n + (p^2+p) / 2)`

```
: f 2dup dup dup * + 2/ -rot * + - ;
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/DJYh)

Answer (score 3):

## [Fourier](http://github.com/beta-decay/fourier), 34 bytes

```
I~No~OI~P>0{1}{@P+N(N^~NO-N~ON)Oo}
```

[**Try it online!**](http://fourier.tryitonline.net/#code=SX5Ob35PSX5QPjB7MX17QFArTihOXn5OTy1Ofk9OKU9vfQ&input=NDIKMA)

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 30 bytes

```
@cmd/cset/a%1-(%1*2+%2+1)*%2/2
```

Takes `n` and `p` as command-line parameters and prints the result without a trailing newline.

Answer (score 3):

### [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 80 bytes

```
GOTO b
lbla
n+1
m-n
i-1
GOTO d
lblb
readIO
n=i
m=n
readIO
lbld
if i a
printInt m
```

Try it online with test cases:
[2,3](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=R09UTyBiCmxibGEKbisxCm0tbgppLTEKR09UTyBkCmxibGIKcmVhZElPCm49aQptPW4KcmVhZElPCmxibGQKaWYgaSBhCnByaW50SW50IG0&input=&args=Mg+Mw)
[100,5](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=R09UTyBiCmxibGEKbisxCm0tbgppLTEKR09UTyBkCmxibGIKcmVhZElPCm49aQptPW4KcmVhZElPCmxibGQKaWYgaSBhCnByaW50SW50IG0&input=&args=MTAw+NQ)
[42,0](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=R09UTyBiCmxibGEKbisxCm0tbgppLTEKR09UTyBkCmxibGIKcmVhZElPCm49aQptPW4KcmVhZElPCmxibGQKaWYgaSBhCnByaW50SW50IG0&input=&args=NDI+MA)
[0,3](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=R09UTyBiCmxibGEKbisxCm0tbgppLTEKR09UTyBkCmxibGIKcmVhZElPCm49aQptPW4KcmVhZElPCmxibGQKaWYgaSBhCnByaW50SW50IG0&input=&args=MA+Mw)
[0,0](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=R09UTyBiCmxibGEKbisxCm0tbgppLTEKR09UTyBkCmxibGIKcmVhZElPCm49aQptPW4KcmVhZElPCmxibGQKaWYgaSBhCnByaW50SW50IG0&input=&args=MA+MA)

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>17</s> 14 bytes

```
N-N*P-sum(0:P)
```

Thanks to billywob for golfing away 3 bytes. Previous answer:

```
N-sum(N+if(P)1:P)
```

Note that 1:0 expands to the vector (1,0) so we need the if(P) condition (or to use `seq_len`, but that is more bytes). Without the condition, we would get the wrong output if P=0.

If P is zero, then the sum expands to `sum(N+NULL)`, then to `sum(numeric(0))`, which is zero.

Comment: Not sure if this qualifies as a full program because it requires N and P to be already defined. Either way using `n-n*p-sum(0:p)` would be shorter anyways :)

Comment: My interpretation of the problem is that N and P are already defined (other answers seem to take this line as well). Golfing point taken though.

Comment: Unless specified otherwise [submissions need to be full programs or callable functions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) not just snippets. Which other answers make the assumption that the variables are already defined?

Comment: I'm not a javascript expert, but it looks like the javascript solution is taking the variables as already defined. That could be my own misunderstanding though. Since N and P were named as such in the problem, I took that as "specified otherwise". If not, then we need a wrapper `function(N,P){...}` or `N=scan();P=scan();...`

Comment: @JDL the javascript entry doesn't take predefined variabled

Comment: does an R expression qualify as a "function-like construct"? Note that in R, an expression is its own class, can be evaluated directly, and is distinct from a snippet.

Comment: taking the variables as already defined, javascript would be 12 bytes `n+p*(~p/2-n)`

Answer (score 3):

## Java, <s>67</s>, 63 bytes

Golfed:

```
int x(int n,int p){return-((p%2<1)?p*p/2+p:p/2*(p+2)+1)+n-p*n;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
int x(int n, int p)
{
    return -((p%2<1) ? p*p/2+p : p/2 * (p+2) + 1) + n - p*n;
}
```

Basically I did some math on the formula. The `n - p*n` part takes care of the all `n`'s in the formula. Then I used a super fun property of summing together linearly increasing set of integers (arithmetic series): I used the sum of first and last integer and then multiply it by `set.length / 2` (I also check for the parity and handle it appropriately).

Try it: https://ideone.com/DEd85A

Comment: You can remove the space between `int n,int p` to save a byte. Also, you can change the `p%2==0` to `p%2<1` to save another byte. -- I wasn't aware you had already posted a Java answer when I posted [my shorter variant with for-loop](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91928/52210). I like your mathematical formula, though, so +1 from me. :)

Comment: Great formula! Using `p%2>0` and switching the order in the ternary you can save a character.

Comment: Oh and also `p/2 *(p+2)` is equal to `p*p/2+p`

Comment: Hehe great improvements :) actually this formula comes from a funny [anecdote](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/qq/database/qq.02.06/jo1.html) :)
@KevinCruijssen nice answer, definitely better than mine :) +1

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, <s>43</s> 40 bytes

```
int c(int n,int p){return n-p*n+p*~p/2;}
```

## Java 8, 19 bytes

```
(n,p)->n-p*n+p*~p/2
```

Shamelessly stolen from [*@JonathanAllan*'s amazing Python 2 formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91915/52210).

**Original answer (<s>61</s> 60 bytes):**

```
int c(int n,int p){int r=n,i=1;for(;i<p;r-=n+++i);return r;}
```

**Ungolfed & test cases:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/cwJp03)

```
class M{
  static int c(int n, int p){
    return n - p*n + p*~p / 2;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c(2, 3));
    System.out.println(c(100, 5));
    System.out.println(c(42, 0));
    System.out.println(c(0, 3));
    System.out.println(c(0, 0));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
-10
-415
42
-6
0
```

Comment: What about this requires Java 7?

Comment: @mbomb007 `int c(int n,int p){...}`. If it would have been Java 8 (or 9) it could have been `(n,p)->n-p*n+p*~p/2` (**19 bytes**)

Comment: Then do that to save those bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 33 Bytes

```
$n-=$n*$p+array_sum(range(0,$p));
```

Comment: I think you need to use `<?php` or short `<?` for PHP-Code. Please edit your answer.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/features.commandline.usage.php not from the command line

Comment: Sorry, forget what said. I have seen many answers with this, and therefore thought, that there is a rule for that, which is not the case. There should be one, to avoid discussions like this one.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
RS+×_×-
```

Arguments are `P, N`
Test it on [**TryItOnline**](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UlMrw5dfw5ct&input=&args=NQ+MTAw)

How?

```
RS+×_×-  - takes two arguments: P, N
R        - range(P): [1,2,3, ... ,P]
 S       - sum: 1+2+3+ ... +P
   ×     - multiply: P*N
  +      - add: 1+2+3+ ... +P + P*N
    _    - subtract: 1+2+3+ ... +P + P*N - N
      -  - -1
     ×   - multiply: (1+2+3+ ... +P + P*N - N)*-1
                   = -1-2-3- ... -P - P*N + N
                   = N - (N+1) - (N+2) - (N+3) - ... - (N+P)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth - 6 bytes

```
-F}Q+E
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-F%7DQ%2BE&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A3%0A100%0A5%0A42%0A0%0A0%0A3%0A0%0A0&debug=0&input_size=2).

Answer (score 2):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 15 bytes

```
?:?:}*-{:)*#/-!
```

or

```
??:}`)*{:)*#/-!
```

Uses the closed form solution `n - n*P - P*(P+1)/2`.

Answer (score 2):

## php, 38 bytes

```
<?=$argv[1]*(1-$a=$argv[2])-$a++*$a/2;
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 12 bytes

```
perz?+{.-}r[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/ILWoyl67Wk@3tij6/39DAwMFUwA)

```
pe     #Read input as P, N
rz     #Range (0,N)
?+     #Add P to each
{.-}r[ #Reduce via subtraction
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
+ṡƒ-
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIr4bmhxpItIiwiIiwiMTAwXG41Il0=)

Port of Jelly answer.

### How?

```
+ṡƒ-
+ṡ   # Inclusive range [a, a + b]
  ƒ- # Reduce by subtraction
```

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 17 bytes

```
Prompt N,P
N-NP-.5(P²+P
```

Alternatives:

```
Prompt N,P
N-P(P/2+.5+N
```

```
Prompt N,P
N-NP-.5P(P+1
```

```
Prompt N,P
N-.5P(2N+P+1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
Ms+Gm_+GdSH
```

A function `g` that takes input of `n` and `p` via argument and prints the result. It can be called in the form `gn p`.

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Ms%2BGm_%2BGdSH%3B%0Ag2+3%3B%0Ag100+5%3B%0Ag42+0%3B%0Ag0+3%3B%0Ag0+0&debug=0)

**How it works**

```
Ms+Gm_+GdSH  Function g. Inputs: G, H
M            g=lambda G,H:
         SH   1-indexed range, yielding [1, 2, 3, ..., H]
    m_+Gd     Map lambda d:-(G+d) over the above, yielding [-(G+1), -(G+2), -(G+3),
              ..., -(G+H)]
  +G          Add G to the above, yielding [G, -(G+1), -(G+2), -(G+3), ..., -(G+H)]
 s            Reduce on addition with base case 0, yielding G-(G+1)-(G+2)-(G+3)...
              -(G+H)
              Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## C89, <s>38</s>, <s>35</s>, 33 bytes

```
h(n,p,r)int*r;{*r=n-p++*(n+p/2);}
```

Test it on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d79b4c81eab66666).

Answer (score 1):

## Maple, 19 bytes

```
n-sum(i,i=n+1..n+p)
```

Usage:

```
> f:=(n,p)->n-sum(i,i=n+1..n+p);
> f(2, 3);
  -10
> f(100,5);
  -415
> f(42,0);
  42
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 21 bytes

```perl6
{$^n-[+] $n^..$n+$^p}
```

### Explanation:

```perl6
# bare block lambda with two placeholder parameters ｢$n｣ and ｢$p｣
{
  $^n -
      # reduce using ｢&infix:<+>｣
      [+]
          # a Range that excludes ｢$n｣ and has ｢$p｣ values after it
          $n ^.. ($n + $^p)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 25 bytes

```
(n,p)->n-(p*n+p*(p+1)/2);
```

## Ungolfed test program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> f = (n, p) -> n - (p * n + p * (p + 1) / 2);
    System.out.println(f.apply(100, 5));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 41 bytes

```
def?(n:Int,p:Int)=n-(1 to p).map{n+_}.sum
```

Testing code:

```
println(?(2,3))
println(?(100,5))
println(?(42,0))
println(?(0,3))
println(?(0,0))

// Output
-10
-415
42
-6
0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure/Clojurescript, 30 bytes

```
#(reduce -(range %(+ 1 % %2)))
```

The straightforward approach is shorter than the mathematically clever ones.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org): 17-18 bytes (13 as program with terminal inputs)

As per suggestion in comments that "function or program" form is needed:

- as function: 17 characters, 18 bytes if you count ∘ as multibyte

  ```
  n∘r=2n-sum(n:n+r)
  ```

  usage: `5∘3` outputs `-16`
- as program, passed initial parameters from terminal: 13 bytes:

  ```
  2n-sum(n:n+r)
  ```

  usage: `julia -E 'n,r=5,3;include("codegolf.jl")'`

Comment: Nice solution, [but all submissions need to be callable functions or full programs](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) not just snippets. I think the shortest fix would be to define it [as a binary operator](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/81028/8478) by prepending `n\r=`.

Comment: Thanks, I edited to that effect. `\ `  is a bad choice because it needs to be explicitly imported, although I suppose this is the kind of thing that could fall under a gray area. (but if I were allowed to do that, I might as well say `Σ(n:n+r)` where `Σ` is an alias for `sum` :p ). An "initialise and call" from the terminal feels like a bit of a cheat, but again it's a gray area, since other submissions do this without problem since it's considered the only way to call the program.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 20 bytes

Subtract the next `B1` integers from `A1`:

```
=A1-B1*(A1+(B1+1)/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 11 bytes

Formula stolen elsewhere...

```
~1$1$)2/+*-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v85QxVBF00hfW0v3/39DAwMFUwA)

### Explanation

This just boils down to

```
A-B*(A+(B+1)/2)
```

Converted to postfix.

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 15 bytes

```
~),{1$+}%{-}*\;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v05Tp9pQRbtWtVq3VivG@v9/QwMDBVMA)

### Explanation

```
~               # Evaluate the input
 ),             # Generate inclusive range
   {1$+}%       # Add each item by the other input
         {-}*   # Reduce by difference
             \; # Discard the extra other input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-hr`, <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
+ɧ^∑$-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//9f@9D@k8vjHnVMVNH9/9/QwIDLlAtI/tfNKAIA)

No formula, just a for loop!

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/a-ee/w) `d`,  <del>6</del> 4 bytes

Surprised to see that it's not short at all. (Although it at least ties with Jelly...)

```
7▄i←
```

### Explanation

Uncompressed:

```
+.@-R
+     % Generate b+a
 .    % Generate range(a,b+a)
  @-R % Reduce via subtraction
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ôV r-
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9FYgci0&input=MiAz)

```
ôV r-     :Implicit input of integers U=N & V=P
ôV        :Range [U,U+V]
   r-     :Reduce by subtraction
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Demsos](https://desmos.com), 20 bytes

```
f(n,p)=n-p(p/2+.5+n)
```

Other 20-byters:

```
f(n,p)=n-pn-p(p+1)/2
f(n,p)=n-pp/2-.5p-np
f(n,p)=n-.5p(2n+p+1)
f(n,p)=n-pn-.5pp-.5p
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ok09b870nw)

With the sum function, it's 27 bytes:

```
f(n,p)=n-∑_{x=n+1}^{n+p}x
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 10 bytes

```
{-/x+!y+1}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6rW1a/QVqzUNqzl4kqLNrI2jgVShgYG1qYghomRtQGINoCIGwB5AFkZDQs=)

Quick.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)), 43 bytes

```python
lambda n,p:n-sum([n+i+1 for i in range(p)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3BCoMwEETP9iv2uIsR1tpCya@EHFLaaqCuS9RDvz51wdubGXijv21aZHhoqZ@lgDhQyAIhXB0M0UHomR3cjW5HxQZ8Tmw5@kujJcuGWL9pfr7SIVEv3brPGKTNbQ9mzqYtScY3KkWqhPZFVP8)

Explanation:

```python
lambda n,p:                                  # Lambda header
                 [n+i+1 for i in range(p)]   # Next P numbers
             sum(                          ) # Sum each number
           n-                                # Subtract from N for final result
```

Comment: My initial answer was 46 bytes, then i shaved off 2 bytes by changing the comprehension, then 1 more byte was shaved off by turning -s into +s and vice versa.

Comment: I think you can remove the brackets

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 14 bytes

```
n0ns-0Rl0I*-&+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z/PIK9Y1yAox8BTS1dN@/9/QwMDLlMA)

This relies on the fact that for X=starting number and Y=iterator, the answer is:

`X - (X*Y) - sum([1..Y])`

It uses the `R` command to generate the range of negative numbers.

```
n              - read starting number onto the stack
 0n            - push "0", read iteration count onto the stack
   s           - save iteration count
    -          - convert to negative number
     0         - push "0" to set ending number
      R        - generate a range of negative numbers
       l       - load the iterator count
        0I     - copy the starting number
          *    - multiple to get base number common to all decrements
           -   - convert to negative (relies on "0" from range)
            &+ - sum the stack, answer prints automatically
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 bytes

```apl
⊣-(+/(⍳⊢)+⊣)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHXYt1NbT1NR71bn7UtUhTG8jX/P@obypQytDAQCFNwZQLwjMCso25/gMA)

Comment: `⊣-1⊥+∘⍳` uses 1⊥ to sum and rearranges (⍳⊢)+⊣ to +∘⍳

Comment: @rak1507 at first I thought `{⍺-+/⍺+⍳⍵}`, but yours seems smaller