# 52 Week Challenge

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, arithmetic, simulation

The 52 week challenge is a way to save money. For example, Week 1, you save $1.00. Week 2 you save $2.00, and it continues through the year, adding one more dollar to each week’s savings goal. By Week 52, you’ll set aside $52.00, which will bring the year’s total savings to $1,378! Of course, you can decide how much money you start saving and how many weeks.

Given an amount for Week 1 and the number of weeks the challenge should run for, return the total amount saved  at the end of the challenge.

Week 2 will have as twice the amount of Week 1, Week 3 will have thrice the amount of Week 1, etc.

#### Examples

`1` and `52` weeks: `1378`

`5` and `6` weeks: `105`

`.25` and `100` weeks: `1262.5`

`10` and `1` week: `10`

`7` and `0` weeks: `0`

`0` and `30` weeks: `0`

`0` and `0` weeks: `0`

Comment: This challenge is very poorly specified; the task is unclear and it lacks any winning or validity criterion. Please respecify it so the exact task is clear and it is easy to determine if a submission is valid and which submissions win.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to PPCG! We generally host programming competitions, and  the challenges here should have a clear specification in order to indisputably decide whether an answer is valid and a winning criterion to determine which submission wins. For guidance, you can visit this meta thread: [How does this site work?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13944) It might be worth reading through [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) too. For future challenges, we can help you improve them with the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140). :-)

Comment: I've edited your post to conform to our standards while following a possible interpretation of your original text. If it doesn't suit you, feel free to [roll the edit back](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/151470/revisions).

Comment: I think this challenge has one thing preventing it being reopened: How does setting aside $52 bring the year's total to $1378? What mapping is being done?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing That's $1+$2+$3+…+$52=$1378.

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate of [sum all integers from 1 to n](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133109/sum-of-all-integers-from-1-to-n), because it requires simply computing that result and multiplying it by another input.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 5 bytes

Takes weeks as the first input and starting amount as the second.

```
õ x*V
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9SB4KlY=&input=NTIsMQ==)

Comment: Alternatively, `õ*V X`

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 6 bytes

```
*2!1+]
```

Takes the amount as the left argument and the weeks as the right argument.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT8tI0VA79n9qcka@gqFCmoKpEReYbQpkm0GYBnpGIJ6hgQGEb2gA4kHY5kAmVBgkaozENvgPAA)

#### Explanation

```
* 2 ! 1 + ]
      1 + ]  Add 1 to the weeks.
  2 !        (Weeks + 1 choose 2)
*            Multiply by the starting amount.
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the nth triangle number is (n+1 choose 2). Perhaps unsurprisingly, [this is almost the exact same answer as the one I have for the sum of digits from 1 to n challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133168/42833). Just substitute `>:` for `1+]` and tack on the `*`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 13 bytes

```
#*(#+1)*#2/2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X1lLQ1nbUFNL2UjfSO1/QFFmXomCg0JatKmRjmHsfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 23 bytes

```r
function(a,w)sum(0:w*a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNRp1yzuDRXw8CqXCtR83@ahqmOmeZ/AA)

Takes input as `a`mount, `w`eeks.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 20 bytes

```python
lambda a,w:a*w*-~w/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFRp9wqUatcS7euXN/of1p@EVBEIUkhM09Bw1DH1EhTR8NUxwxI6hmZ6hgaGABZhgY6hkDKXAfEMdAxhlAGmlZcCgoFRZl5JRppGok6SZqa/wE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
R×S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o8PTg////m/03BQA)