# Measuring Mountains

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

[Sum-It](https://github.com/dylanrenwick/sum-it) is a language I created (quite late) for the Language Design Contest in TNB, for which the theme was "Range". Naturally I interpreted this as "Mountain Range" and created a language about mountains.

Sum-It code takes the form of several ASCII art mountains, using only the `/` and `\` characters. The mountains are then parsed to a number representing the size of the mountain, and that number is used as either an opcode or a data value.

While developing the parser for this language, I noticed something quite interesting regarding mountain sizes:

The size of a standalone (ie: not overlapped) mountain is equivalent to double the sum of all integers lower than the mountain's height in characters.

So for example, the following mountain:

```
  /\   <- 1
 /  \  <- 2
/    \ <- 3
```

Has a character height of 3. Its "size" as far as Sum-It is concerned, is calculated as such:

```
  /\
 /##\
/####\
```

And is therefore 6.
This lines up with the above formula, because the sum of all integers lower than 3 is `1 + 2 = 3`, which doubled is 6.

### The challenge

Your challenge is, given a positive integer representing a mountain's height, output the Sum-It size of the mountain, using the above formula.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes wins!

### Test Cases

Test cases are represented as `input => output => formula`

```
1 => 0 => 2()
2 => 2 => 2(1)
3 => 6 => 2(1+2)
4 => 12 => 2(1+2+3)
5 => 20 => 2(1+2+3+4)
6 => 30 => 2(1+2+3+4+5)
7 => 42 => 2(1+2+3+4+5+6)
8 => 56 => 2(1+2+3+4+5+6+7)
9 => 72 => 2(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8)
10 => 90 => 2(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)
15 => 210 => 2(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14)
20 => 380 => 2(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19)
25 => 600 => 2(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24)
30 => 870 => 2(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29)
40 => 1560 => 2(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39)
50 => 2450 => 2(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39+40+41+42+43+44+45+46+47+48+49)
60 => 3540 => 2(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39+40+41+42+43+44+45+46+47+48+49+50+51+52+53+54+55+56+57+58+59)
70 => 4830 => 2(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39+40+41+42+43+44+45+46+47+48+49+50+51+52+53+54+55+56+57+58+59+60+61+62+63+64+65+66+67+68+69)
80 => 6320 => 2(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39+40+41+42+43+44+45+46+47+48+49+50+51+52+53+54+55+56+57+58+59+60+61+62+63+64+65+66+67+68+69+70+71+72+73+74+75+76+77+78+79)
90 => 8010 => 2(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39+40+41+42+43+44+45+46+47+48+49+50+51+52+53+54+55+56+57+58+59+60+61+62+63+64+65+66+67+68+69+70+71+72+73+74+75+76+77+78+79+80+81+82+83+84+85+86+87+88+89)
100 => 9900 => 2(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39+40+41+42+43+44+45+46+47+48+49+50+51+52+53+54+55+56+57+58+59+60+61+62+63+64+65+66+67+68+69+70+71+72+73+74+75+76+77+78+79+80+81+82+83+84+85+86+87+88+89+90+91+92+93+94+95+96+97+98+99)
```

Comment: "*using the above formula.*" so, the code **has** to calculate all these additions?

Comment: Basically 2×[triangular number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133109/sum-of-all-integers-from-1-to-n?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @FelixPalmen no, provided it outputs the correct answer

Comment: @Skidsdev good! unfortunately, makes it too simple once you found the simpler formula ;)

Comment: @user202729 hmm good point, given that challenge I think this one is really just a trivial modification to that challenge, with context around it. Guess I should've stuck to my original idea which was to take the ASCII mountains as input and output the size of the mountains.

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
+/2×⍳⎕
```

Prompts for input integer, creates a vector of integers from 1 to integer -1, multiplies by 2 and sums the result.

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Adam by switching to index origin zero.

Comment: Save two bytes by using `⎕IO←0` and removing `-1`. Save an additional byte by switching to Dyalog APL and removing `⎕`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/7X1jQ5Pf9S7@X8akPuotw8i09V8aL3xo7aJQF5wkDOQDPHwDP6fpmDIBcQGYMIAAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Adám Thanks for the two bytes which was of course trivial. Switching to Dyalog not so trivial ;(

Comment: Why not? [Apply for a free license](http://dss.dyalog.com/apply.php?ltype=pe) or [use unregistered version](https://www.dyalog.com/download-zone/unregistered.htm) or just [use TryAPL](https://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395IO%u21900%20%u22C4%20f%u2190+/2%D7%u2373%20%u22C4%20f%A81%2010%20100%201000&run).

Comment: @Adám I am conscious that we should take this elsewhere but I was sent a copy of v13 several years ago by some guys I know in Dyalog but the effort of converting the vast library of code I have in APL+WIN seemed overwhelming. I commented before that I might migrate when an Android version emerges

Comment: [Let's continue this conversation in chat…](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 31 bytes

```c
i;f(n,a){for(;--n;i+=n);a=i*2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dh9z/TOk0jTydRszotv0jDWlc3zzpT2zZP0zrRNlPLyLr2f2ZeiUJuYmaehiZXNVdBEZCbpqGkmhKTp6STpmGoqWmNKWiAVdQUm6gZWG3tfwA)

EDIT: By using a global variable multiple execution of the functions wil lget wrong results. I'm not sure wether that's ok or no. Pretty new to PPCG.

Here's the corrected version:

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 34 bytes

```c
f(n,i,a){for(i=0;--n;i+=n);a=i*2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dh9z9NI08nUydRszotv0gj09bAWlc3zzpT2zZP0zrRNlPLyLr2f2ZeiUJuYmaehiZXNVdBEZCbpqGkmhKTp6STpmFoqqlpjSFqZgASrf0PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-mx`, 1 bytes

```
Ñ
```

`-m` implicity flag creates a range from `0` to `input - 1`

`Ñ` multiply each value in the range by 2

Flag `-x` implicity outputs the sum of the result

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///DE//8tFXRzKwA)

Comment: [1 byte](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=0Q==&input=OAotbXg=) with the `-mx` flag.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 13 bytes

```c
f(x){x*=x--;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCsIwFET3OcVQKeTbRtBtmp7ETUmMBvRXaoVAydnT39k8mPe8eXpfT4n9@x8eGH5rSPPlNdaoM2357LIxttTEKz5TYk1qU0CcF@jjYzhcrWDATdh1TKKPRPZdJIm6aQPciDbcuem5j5qJrBRFlboD)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 10 bytes

```hs
(*)=<<pred
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##LYpLDoIwAAX3nuKFuAD5pKDswBPoyiUQ02BLjaU2bQ23t1J192bmCWofTErP0aL38S5pm0YbdvMzvavVzVSfr4h7lR@hX@7izElhCyueCxTSFBHWEoX1dTGHShI4Zp3FIphhG/ypRVcWRUmGcO7KOqtIVtU/2pPsQEIkg3@PXNLJ@nzU@gM), using [`(<*>)`](https://tio.run/##LYpBDoIwAATvvmJDPLRQSItyE16gJ49ATINFjFAbWsPvrVS97czsIO1DjaPvUaLxJKaHuDKzuvpJ3vXqJmlOF5BGpxXMy53dfNTYwg7PBRpJgghricL6OtJDUwqnrLNYBjWrDf5UohZZJngbzrUoWM5ZXvxox9meh8hb/@76Ud6sTztjPg) would work too since multiplication is commutative..

### Alternative, 9 bytes

I'm not completely sure if this is allowed, according to [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12747/48198) I believe it is:

```hs
id<>(-1+)
```

Takes input as `Product` type, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU9Na4NAEL37Kx6hFEV30bS5hOilpVBooJBjEsqiqy7Vddkdkfz52rWRHgbexzzmTSvct@y6WfVmsIRXQYIfBz2oCiE@7VCNJYWcR0gQHooIURDUyHGZVXUoQpbF0dwLpb3UC3P8QnjRrIAZ6UT2Q@MBrh0maMQxNvDOZkF/WjhZYd6gowgkHTlMrbQywMpynDPOs/S6BM7ZLtmmyXZ3Z09p8pwuZnoNfIAxvAzakfVdcRp7Rjcj8QhjJdGNGas0Kd34zfvJ/R7vmmQj7dJohf9ujkbS@jk4aj8rm3/KuhONm1lpzC8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Catholicon](https://github.com/okx-code/Catholicon), 2 bytes

```
*Ẏ
```

Explanation:

```
*    multiply (the implicit input)
 Ẏ   by the implicit input decremented
```