# A cube of text ݀

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, geometry, grid

Last time you made [a square of text](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/88926/a-square-of-text), but now, can you make a **cube** of text?

### The Challenge

Given a string, output the string in the form of a cube.

You can assume the string will always have 2 chars or more, and will only have printable ascii characters.

### How to Make a Text Cube

[image: terrible mspaint skills.png]

### Test Cases

```
Input:
Test

Output:
   Test
  e  ss
 s  e e
tseT  T
s  e e
e  ss
Test

Input:
Hello, world!

Output:
            Hello, world!
           e           dd
          l           l l
         l           r  r
        o           o   o
       ,           w    w

     w           ,      ,
    o           o       o
   r           l        l
  l           l         l
 d           e          e
!dlrow ,olleH           H
d           e          e
l           l         l
r           l        l
o           o       o
w           ,      ,

,           w    w
o           o   o
l           r  r
l           l l
e           dd
Hello, world!

Input:
Hi

Output:
 Hi
iHH
Hi
```

### Reference Implementation in Python

```python
text = raw_input("Enter a string: ")

print " " * (len(text) - 1) + text

spaces = len(text) - 2
_spaces = spaces

for i in range(1, len(text) - 2 + 1):
    print " " * spaces + text[i] + " " * _spaces + text[(i + 1) * -1] + " " * (_spaces - spaces) + text[(i + 1) * -1]
    spaces -= 1

print text[::-1] + " " * _spaces + text[0]

spaces = _spaces - 1

for i in range(1, len(text) - 2 + 1):
    print text[(i + 1) * -1] + " " * _spaces + text[i] + " " * spaces + text[i]
    spaces -= 1

print text
```

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins! Tiebreaker is most upvoted.
- Standard loopholes are disallowed.
- Trailing newline and trailing spaces are allowed.

### Leaderboard

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 92410; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 48934; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    if (/<a/.test(lang)) lang = jQuery(lang).text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang > b.lang) return 1;
    if (a.lang < b.lang) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Winners by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are trailing spaces allowed?

Comment: @Neil Yes. (15 chars)

Comment: Just curious, what's with the additional characters in the challenge title?

Comment: @TimmyD "A cube of text" is 14 characters long, the title needs to be at least 15 characters long, so I added a small dot. [I think it's this one.](http://unicode-table.com/en/0740/)

Comment: Ah, OK. It shows up as a [much larger circle](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kJP29.png) in IE on my computer, hence my question.

Comment: May I draw it with the backlines visible as well? As if you did the wireframe approach?

Comment: @carusocomputing no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pyth, 78 bytes

```
AtBtlQJ_SH
+*dGQVJs[*Nd@Q-GN*dHK@QN*d-HNK;
++_Q*dHhQVJs[@QN*dH@Q-GN*dtN@Q-GN;
```

With trailing newline.   Inspired by Joshua de Haan's Python 3 answer.

[Try it online here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=AtBtlQJ_SH%0A%2B%2adGQVJs%5B%2aNd%40Q-GN%2adHK%40QN%2ad-HNK%3B%0A%2B%2B_Q%2adHhQVJs%5B%40QN%2adH%40Q-GN%2adtN%40Q-GN%3B%0A&input=%22head%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>228</s> <s>223</s> <s>221</s> <s>203</s> <s>199</s> <s>195</s> 189

```python
t=input()
x=" "
l=len(t)-1
q=l-1
f=range(q,0,-1)
print x*l+t
for i in f:print x*i+t[l-i]+x*q+t[i]+x*(q-i)+t[i]
print t[::-1]+x*q+t[0]
for i in f:print t[i]+x*q+t[l-i]+x*(i-1)+t[l-i]
print t
```

## Python 3, <s>192</s> <s>188</s> 182

```python
t=input()
x=" "
l=len(t)-1
q=l-1
p=print
f=range(q,0,-1)
p(x*l+t)
for i in f:p(x*i+t[l-i]+x*q+t[i]+x*(q-i)+t[i])
p(t[::-1]+x*q+t[0])
for i in f:p(t[i]+x*q+t[l-i]+x*(i-1)+t[l-i])
p(t)
```

Comment: [That's 203 bytes.](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter) Also, you can save 4 bytes by replacing `raw_input()` with `input()`.

Comment: Right you are, thanks!

Comment: `x*(q)`? You should be able to remove the parens, yes?

Comment: You're right, silly me ;) Fixing it now haha

Comment: `x*(i-1)` -> `x*~-i`

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>148</s> 144 bytes

+1 byte from the `n` flag. Shows newlines instead of semicolons for readability (same functionality).

```
S=" "
X=S*s=$_.size-2
puts X+S+I=$_,(r=1..s).map{|i|c=I[~i];S*(s-i+1)+I[i]+X+c+S*~-i+c},I.reverse+X+I[0],r.map{|i|c=I[i];I[~i]+X+c+S*(s-i)+c},I
```

Run like so. Input is a line of STDIN, with no trailing newline, so it likely needs to be piped from file.

```
ruby -ne 'S=" ";X=S*s=$_.size-2;puts X+S+I=$_,(r=1..s).map{|i|c=I[~i];S*(s-i+1)+I[i]+X+c+S*~-i+c},I.reverse+X+I[0],r.map{|i|c=I[i];I[~i]+X+c+S*(s-i)+c},I'
```

Answer (score 3):

## x86 (IA-32) machine code, 126 bytes

Hexdump:

```
60 8b f9 57 33 c0 f2 ae 5e 2b fe 4f 87 fa 8d 1c
12 8b c3 48 f6 e3 c6 04 07 00 48 c6 04 07 20 75
f9 8b ea 4d 53 8d 04 2a 50 53 8b c5 f6 e3 8d 44
68 01 50 53 2b c2 8b c8 50 4b 53 55 53 03 c5 50
f7 d3 53 50 53 95 f6 e2 6b c0 04 50 43 53 51 6a
01 4a 52 6a 01 50 6a ff 51 b0 0a 6a 0b 8b dc 59
8b 6c cb fc 88 04 2f 03 2c cb 89 6c cb fc 83 f9
0a 75 01 ac e2 ea 4a 79 e0 83 c4 58 61 c3
```

This is a bit long, so to explain it I'll give C code first:

```
void doit(const char* s, char out[])
{
    int n = strlen(s);
    int w = 2 * n;
    int h = w - 1;
    int m = n - 1;

    memset(out, ' ', h * w);
    out[h * w] = 0;

    int offset1 = n + m;
    int offset2 = w * m + 2 * m + 1; // 2 * n * n - 1
    int offset3 = offset2 - n; // 2 * n * n - n - 1
    int offset4 = 4 * n * m; // 4 * n * n - 4 * n

    int offsets[] = {
        offset3, -1,
        offset4, 1,
        m, 1,
        offset3, 1 - w,
        offset4, -w,
        offset2 - 1, -w,
        offset2 - 1, w - 1,
        m, w - 1,
        offset3, w,
        offset2, w,
        offset1, w,
    };

    do
    {
        char c = *s++;
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
        {
            if (i == 9)
                c = '\n';
            int offset = offsets[i * 2];
            assert(offset > 0 && offset < w * h);
            out[offset] = c;
            offsets[i * 2] += offsets[i * 2 + 1];
        }
    } while (--n);
}
```

Here `n` is the length of the input string.

The dimensions of the output area are `2n` (width) by `2n-1` (height). First, it fills everything with spaces (and adds a terminating null byte). Then, it travels along 11 straight lines in the output area, and fills them with text:

- 2 lines are filled with end-of-line bytes (=10)
- 9 lines are filled with the consecutive bytes of the input string

Each line is represented by two numbers, a start offset and a stride. I stuffed them both into the array `offsets`, to make access "easy".

The interesting part is filling the array. There is little importance for the order of the entries in the array; I tried to rearrange them to minimize the number of register conflicts. In addition, quadratic formulas have some freedom in choosing the way of calculation; I tried to minimize the number of subtractions (because additions can be implemented by the flexible `LEA` instruction).

Assembly source:

```
    pushad;

    ; // Calculate the length of the input string
    mov edi, ecx;
    push edi;
    xor eax, eax;
    repne scasb;
    pop esi; // esi = input string
    sub edi, esi;
    dec edi;

    ; // Calculate the size of the output area
    xchg edi, edx;  // edx = n
                    // edi = output string
    lea ebx, [edx + edx]; // ebx = w
    mov eax, ebx;
    dec eax; // eax = h
    mul bl; // eax = w * h

    ; // Fill the output string with spaces and zero terminate it
    mov byte ptr [edi + eax], 0;
myfill:
    dec eax;
    mov byte ptr [edi + eax], ' ';
    jnz myfill;

    mov ebp, edx;
    dec ebp; // ebp = m

    ; // Fill the array of offsets
    push ebx; // w
    lea eax, [edx + ebp];
    push eax; // offset1
    push ebx; // w
    mov eax, ebp;
    mul bl;
    lea eax, [eax + 2 * ebp + 1];
    push eax; // offset2
    push ebx; // w
    sub eax, edx;
    mov ecx, eax; // ecx = offset3
    push eax; // offset3
    dec ebx;
    push ebx; // w - 1
    push ebp; // m
    push ebx; // w - 1
    add eax, ebp;
    push eax; // offset2 - 1
    not ebx;
    push ebx; // -w
    push eax; // offset2 - 1
    push ebx; // -w
    xchg eax, ebp; // eax = m
    mul dl;
    imul eax, eax, 4;
    push eax; // offset4
    inc ebx;
    push ebx; // 1 - w
    push ecx; // offset3
    push 1;
    dec edx; // edx = n - 1
    push edx;
    push 1;
    push eax;
    push -1;
    push ecx;

    ; // Use the array of offsets to write stuff to output
myout:
    mov al, '\n';
    push 11;
    mov ebx, esp;
    pop ecx;
myloop:
    mov ebp, [ebx + ecx * 8 - 4];
    mov [edi + ebp], al;
    add ebp, [ebx + ecx * 8];
    mov [ebx + ecx * 8 - 4], ebp;
    cmp ecx, 10;
    jne skip_read;
    lodsb;
skip_read:
    loop myloop;
    dec edx;
    jns myout;

    add esp, 11 * 8;

    popad;
    ret;
```

I used byte multiplications here, limiting the length of the input string to 127. This avoids clobbering the register `edx` - the product is calculated in `ax` instead.

A minor glitch: when filling the array, the length of the string gets decreased by 1. So I adjusted the loop exit condition:

```
    jns myout
```

It counts down to -1.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript, <s>225</s> 198 bytes

Saved 27 bytes thanks to @Neil

```js
f=(s,l=s.length-2,d=' ',r='repeat',t=d[r](l))=>[d+t+s,...a=[...Array(l)].map((_,i)=>d[r](l-i)+s[i+1]+t+(p=s[l-i])+d[r](i)+p),[...s].reverse().join``+t+s[0],...a.map(v=>v.trim()).reverse(),s].join`
`
```

- [...] instead of .concat
- [...]+map instead of *for* loop
- only one statement by moving variables as function parameters
- better initialization for *l* and *t*

**Original answer:**

```js
f=s=>{l=s.length,d=' ',r='repeat',a=[],t=d[r](l-2)+s;for(i=1;i++<l-1;)a.push(d[r](l-i)+s[i-1]+d[r](l-2)+(p=s[l-i])+d[r](i-2)+p);console.log(d+[t].concat(a,[...t].reverse().join``+s[0],a.map(v=>v.trim()).reverse(),s).join`
`)}
```

Comment: Nice, although golfable: `(s,l=s.length-2,d=' ',r='repeat',t=d[r](l))=>[d+t+s,...a=[...Array(l)].map((_,i)=>d[r](l-i)+s[i+1]+t+(p=s[l-i])+d[r](i)+p),[...s].reverse().join\`\`+t+s[0],...a.map(v=>v.trim()).reverse(),s].join\`\n\`` (using `\n` because you can't put newlines in comments).

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, 283 bytes

```
void a(String s){int h=s.length(),n=h*2-1,t=n-h,u=n-1;char[][]c=new char[n][n];for(int i=0;i<h;i++){c[0][t+i]=c[i][t-i]=c[t][t-i]=c[t+i][t]=c[t+i][u-i]=c[t-i][t+i]=c[t-i][u]=c[u][i]=c[u-i][0]=s.charAt(i);}for(int y=0;y<n;y++){System.out.println(new String(c[y]).replace('\0',' '));}}
```

[**Try it here!**](https://ideone.com/si1aKH)

**Ungolfed:**

```
void a(String s) {
    int length=s.length(),
        n=length*2-1,
        mid=n-length,
        doubleMid=n-1;
    char[][]c=new char[n][n];
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
        c[0][mid+i]= 
        c[i][mid-i]=
        c[mid][mid-i]=
        c[mid+i][mid]=
        c[mid+i][doubleMid-i]=
        c[mid-i][mid+i]=
        c[mid-i][doubleMid]=
        c[doubleMid][i]=
        c[doubleMid-i][0]=s.charAt(i);
    }
    for(int y=0;y<n;y++){
        System.out.println(new String(c[y]).replace('\0',' '));
    }
}
```