# Try to make a cube!

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

Based on this: [Make me a square!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/120052/try-to-make-a-square)

You need to output this:

```
  ####
 # # #
###  #
# # #
####
```

Where "#" is replaced with the input.

If you input "A", you should get

```
  AAAA
 A A A
AAA  A
A A A
AAAA
```

If you input "&", you should get

```
  &&&&
 & & &
&&&  &
& & &
&&&&
```

### Leaderboard

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 121651; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 48934; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    if (/<a/.test(lang)) lang = jQuery(lang).text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang > b.lang) return 1;
    if (a.lang < b.lang) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Winners by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, this is somewhat similar, although at least it's not a 3-byte answer in Charcoal this time...

Comment: @Neil it will probably be 4 bytes. Formula: `b=d+1` where b is the number of bytes and d is the number of dimensions used.

Comment: Can the last two lines have leading spaces and can the result have leading newlines?

Comment: @dzaima yes, they can.

Comment: `Ｂ³Ｓ‖Ｏ↗` it may very well be close to a 10 byte answer in charcoal though... I just don't know the language well enough to do it, there really needs to be a page [like this](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/info.txt) but for charcoal.

Comment: [*Wishing that I understood charcoal inputs*](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@/9@z6JDm9/v2fyobSKYnA4ngTKPGrccWgaWVnjUNhksM0kBgmce2gTk//8fwYUFAgA)

Comment: Leading space in each row aligned? That would give the pattern shifted 1 unit right

Comment: It would have helped a lot if a bigger cube was used so that hardcoding wasn't so darn hard to beat.

Comment: @xnor i will make a better one. what is the sandbox

Comment: @AAlex [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/20260)

Comment: I don't see how this is a dupe of the square one

Comment: @LuisMendo this definitely not a dupe. There isn't a single answer that you could port from that question to this one.

Comment: @Satan'sSon I'm not voting to reopen because I would (un)hammer it. Feel free to vote yourself

Comment: "Hammer it"? What's that? @LuisMendo

Comment: When you have a gold badge in one of the challenge's tags, you can single-handedly close it as a dupe, and I think you can undo a dupe-close too; no other people's votes needed

Comment: @carusocomputing [Here](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Commands), and [here](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Operators)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92410/a-cube-of-text-%DD%80?rq=1)

Answer (score 19):

## [Carrot](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/), 31 bytes

```
  ####
 # # #
###  #
# # #
####
```

`#`s are replaced by the input.

Basically a port of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120079/65836), to this problem.

Comment: that looks like it took hours to golf...

Comment: @KritixiLithos 200 rep because you made a cool language, this doesn't seem fair xD

Answer (score 13):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
ð‚•nxвΛ•2вèJ6ô»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@394w6OGWY8aFuVVXNh0bjaQYXRh0@EVXmaHtxza/f@/FgA)

**Explanation**

```
ð‚                # push the list [<input>,<space>]
  •nxвΛ•          # push the number 816342339
        2в        # convert to list of base 2 digits
          è       # index into the the 2-char string with this list
           J      # join to string
            6ô    # split into pieces of length 6
              »   # join on newlines
```

Comment: Can you encode the newline within the list/number to save the last 3 bytes?

Comment: @Rod That'd be a much larger number, 6 bytes at the very least, plus an extra byte or two to include the newline in the list...

Comment: @Rod: You could do something like [this](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@/@oYdnh/QpcjxoWBZmd23p407ltWTZAjvGFTYdXeP3/rwUA). Unfortunately that turns out a bit longer. Good idea though.

Comment: `•nxвΛ•bTRð¹ì‡6ô»`... yours beats transliterate slightly, only due to the ordering requirements; if I could figure out a way to implicitly take input and generate the string `01` in 1-byte, this would be a 13/14 byte solution.

Comment: @carusocomputing `•nxвΛ•bTð¹«‡6ô»` or `ð«T•nxвΛ•br‡6ô»` is same length.

Comment: @Emigna I meant if I could reorder `‡` to be `c.replace(b -> a)`, but that's not really possible. Heh. Smart organization of that reverse though.

Answer (score 12):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 62 bytes

```
./v<.o;.@?/;w.w;i:::::NrSs::SrSuUS::sN::rS:r:srNr:SrSsNs:::SSv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cubix#FcmxDYAwDETRYeid/owEE7g5MQQV0lkk4zvJL98va/20z@2@mg8b/mIXYgIU/4dABiBCSIW2ZqwLslcdEw) and [Watch the interpreter!](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=Li92PC5vOy5APy87Li53O2k6Ojo6Ok5yU3M6OlNyU3VVUzo6c046OnJTOnI6c3JOcjpTclNzTnM6OjpTU3Y=&input=Qg==&speed=5)

This fits onto a 4-cube:

```
        . / v <
        . o ; .
        @ ? / ;
        . . w ;
i : : : : : N r S s : : S r S u
U S : : s N : : r S : r : s r N
r : S r S s N s : : : S S v . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
        . . . .
        . . . .
        . . . .
        . . . .
```

I'm not very good at manipulating the direction of the instruction pointer, so I will continue to try and golf this. Both this and my answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121693/67312) are based on the "Hello, World!' example program using `./v.o;@?/` (on a 3-cube) to recursively print and pop the characters on the stack, so the rest of the code is just pushing the characters onto the stack in the right order.

I have now made a cube on a cube, so I can rest easy (and do my actual work).

Answer (score 9):

## [SOGL](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>13</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
Βū&⁵'r⁹‘6n
```

Explanation:

```
Βū&⁵'r⁹‘    push "  ŗŗŗŗ ŗ ŗ ŗŗŗŗ  ŗŗ ŗ ŗ ŗŗŗŗ", where "ŗ" is replaced with input
        6n  split into lines of length 6
```

Comment: How is this sitting at 0? Probably due to lack of a TIO ._. +1

Comment: I think that there's gonna be at (hopefully) most 1 more update breaking stuff and then I'll think about some online running thing

Comment: Son Of a Golfing Language?

Comment: @ETHproductions lol

Comment: String Oriented Golfing Language

Answer (score 9):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>13</s> 10 bytes

*Thanks to Conor O'Brien for removing 3 bytes, and for showing me that unprintables can be used in Octave.*

The code contains unprintable characters. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@6/OL2qpZaPupJX8/7@6ozoA)

#### Explanation

```
'....'   % Push 5-char string (contains unprintables). Each char encodes a row
         % of the desired pattern
B        % Convert to binary. Gives a 5×6 binary matrix with the pattern
*        % Implicit input. Multiply element-wise (converts input to ASCII code)
c        % Convert to char. Implicitly display. Char 0 is shown as space
```

Comment: You can make this 10 bytes if you're okay with unprintables. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@6/OL2qpZaPupJX8/7@6ozoA "MATL – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Hey, thanks! I wasn't sure Octave was okay with those... how did you even type them?

Comment: Well, I honestly I took the numbers, converted them to hex, then did `echo 0f15392a3c|xxd -r -p|clip`. On windows, `clip` is the clipboard. Then I just pasted them :P (If you're on a command line, it's `^O^U` as well)

Comment: @ConorO'Brien That's way over my head. You should really post that as your answer

Comment: It uses the same tactic as yours does, just removing the need for modulo 64 by using the values directly.

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, 52 Bytes

```php
<?=strtr("  0000
 0 0 0
000  0
0 0 0
0000",0,$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVVJWsuayt/tvY29bXFJUUqShpKBgAARcCgYgyAVkKoAoGMdAScdAB6xV0/r/fwA)

Answer (score 6):

### [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 20 bytes

```
"OUyj|"®c ¤Åd0S1U +R
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=Ik9VeWp8Iq5jIKTFZDBTMVUgK1I=&input=IkEi)

Not too bad for a language with no built-in compression (well, except compressing strings of lowercase letters)...

#### Explanation

In binary, the five characters in the string are:

```
O 1001111
U 1010101
y 1111001
j 1101010
| 1111100
```

Slice off the initial `1` from each, and you get the pattern for the cube.

```
"OUyj|"®   c ¤  Å  d0S1U +R
"OUyj|"mZ{Zc s2 s1 d0S1U +R}  // Expanded
                              // Implicit: U = input string
"OUyj|"mZ{                 }  // Replace each character Z in this string with this function:
          Zc                  //   Take the char-code of Z.
             s2               //   Convert to a binary string.
                s1            //   Slice off the first character (always a "1").
                   d0S1U      //   Replace "0"s with spaces and "1"s with the input.
                         +R   //   Append a newline.
                              // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Comment: I tried a template-based approach (`ll` can be compressed), but it's 11 bytes longer.

Comment: Nice. I was down to 23 bytes before I realised I'd made a balls of it!

Answer (score 6):

## LOLCODE, <s>202</s> 170 bytes

```
I HAS A c
GIMMEH c
VISIBLE"  "AN c AN c AN c AN c AN":) "AN c AN" "AN c AN" "AN c AN":)"AN c AN c AN c AN"  "AN c AN":)"AN c AN" "AN c AN" "AN c AN":)"AN c AN c AN c AN c
```

In LOLCODE, not much to golf...

This sets the variable `c` into the input, and creates a giant concatenated string including `:)` newlines. That's about it.

Comment: `expected HAI at: I` https://tio.run/nexus/lolcode#@@@p4OEYrOCokMzl7unr6@oBZIR5Bns6@bgqBPv6@wd7KCgpAJGjn0IyFkLJShNJUgkX20oTmwkoBqOoIdGgZAVfb8fI//@VAQ

Comment: Also, `VISIBLE` implicitly concatenates, so you can remove `SMOOSH` https://tio.run/nexus/lolcode#@@/h6KlgqGfE5ang4Ris4KiQzOXu6evr6gFkhHkGezr5uCooKQCRo59CMhZCyUoTSVIJF9tKE5sJKAajqCHRoGQu7xCPCKdI1///lQE

Comment: To your first thing, there are some interpreters that don't require HAI or KTHXBYE, e.g. REPL.it. To your second thing, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

## Sed, 40 characters

```
s/./  &&&&\
 & & &\
&&&  &\
& & &\
&&&&/
```

Almost cheating as the challenge description contained it almost literally.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ sed 's/./  &&&&\
 & & &\
&&&  &\
& & &\
&&&&/' <<< 'C'
  CCCC
 C C C
CCC  C
C C C
CCCC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#@1@sr6evoKAGBDFcCmogGMMF5CiAaThXTf//f2cA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 61 bytes

```python
lambda c:"""  ####
 # # #
###  #
# # #
####""".replace('#',c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiQbKWkpKSgoAwEXArKIMgFZCqAKBhHGahCryi1ICcxOVVDXVldJ1nzf0FRZl6JQpqGuqO6JheYwwUXUlPX/A8A)

Answer (score 5):

## Z80 Assembly, 37 bytes machine code

Assume a memory mapped I/O device:

```
; DO NOT INPUT A SPACE or it will go into infinite loop printing spaces & newlines!

3A xx xx    ld  a, (input)  ; get input character
11 0A 20    ld  de, 200ah   ; space & newline
21 yy yy    ld  hl, output  ; get output address
4F          ld  c, a        ; put character in c
loop:
72          ld  (hl), d     ; output space * 2       | output character * 2
72          ld  (hl), d
77          ld  (hl), a     ; output character       | output character
71          ld  (hl), c     ; output character * 2   | output space * 2
71          ld  (hl), c
77          ld  (hl), a     ; output character       | output character
73          ld  (hl), e     ; output newline         | output newline
72          ld  (hl), d     ; output space           | output character
71          ld  (hl), c     ; output character       | output space
72          ld  (hl), d     ; output space           | output character
71          ld  (hl), c     ; output character       | output space
72          ld  (hl), d     ; output space           | output character
B9          cp  c           ; set zero flag 1st time | clear 2nd time
20 06       jr  nz, end     ; skip to end
77          ld  (hl), a     ; output character
73          ld  (hl), e     ; output newline
4A          ld  c, d        ; put space in c
57          ld  d, a        ; put character in d
28 FB       jr  z, loop     ; loop to 2nd time
end:
73          ld  (hl), e     ; output newline
77          ld  (hl), a     ; output character * 4
77          ld  (hl), a
77          ld  (hl), a
77          ld  (hl), a
76          halt            ; or C9 ret
```

Answer (score 4):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 27 bytes

```
4äl2>>Äyvho3pÄÙ3älWx<<3Îd^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/3@TwkhwjO7vDLZVlGfnSxgWHWw7PNAaKhVfY2Bgf7kuJ@//fEQA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 34e4 6c32 3e3e c479 7668 6f1b 3370 c4d9  4.l2>>.yvho.3p..
00000010: 33e4 6c57 783c 3c33 ce64 5e              3.lWx<<3.d^
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can replace `o<esc>` with just `ï`

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
ＳβＧＨ7+↗→³β→Ｇ↓↙³β
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0JLikKDMvXSNJkysgP6cyPT/PIz8nJ79cw8pcwUpbwSq0ICgzPaNEwQpM6SgY6ygkaVpz@eaXpWpAxIA8qE4NK5f88jwFMOmTmgZX/f9/xH/dsv@6xTkA) Link is to verbose version of code. Longer than I wanted it to be, because the "cube" is slightly wider than it is tall or deep. Fortunately some of the multidirectional characters work with PolygonHollow, which saves me 3 bytes. Edit: Saved a further byte by using + instead of T↑. Explanation:

```
Ｓβ          Input the character
ＧＨ7+↗→³β    Draw the left half. 7 becomes ←↙ and + becomes →↓←↑.
→           Move right one character.
Ｇ↓↙³β       Draw the right half.
```

At the time of the challenge, the `q` variable didn't work in verbose mode, otherwise I could have created this 14-byte version:

```
ＧＨ7+↗→³θ→Ｇ↓↙³θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8gP6cyPT/PIz8nJ79cw8pcwUpbwSq0ICgzPaNEwQpM6SgY6ygUalpz@eaXpWpAxIA8qE4NK5f88jwFMOmTmgZX/f9/xH/dsv@6xTkA)

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 72 bytes

I made this one just for the fun of it, since there's already a better PHP answer.

```
for($i=0;$i<27;)echo('00'.decbin(64349871))[$i]?$argn:' ',++$i%6?'':'
';
```

---

The cube is drawn by getting the binary value of `64349871`, concatenated by `'00'`.
This returns the following:

```
0011110101011110011010101111
```

Every 6th character, I'm outputting a newline, resulting in this:

```
001111
010101
111001
101010
1111
```

And, instead of displaying `0`, it displays a space, which will look like:

```
  1111
 1 1 1
111  1
1 1 1 
1111
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 31 bytes

```
' '\+$'9*<'#.2 tb[6 dpad]map#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/stacked#U3dU/6@uoB6jraLOL2qpZaOurGekUJIUbaaQUpCYEpubWKD8P7@05D8A)

Here's a hexdump:

```
λ xxd try-to-make-a-cube.stk
00000000: 2720 275c 2b24 270f 1539 2a3c 2723 2e32  ' '\+$'..9*<'#.2
00000010: 2074 625b 3620 6470 6164 5d6d 6170 23     tb[6 dpad]map#
```

This converts a character array to binary, pads each row to length `6`, and indexes it according to the string `' ' input +`

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, <s>25</s> <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
jcsm?d\ zjC"0¨eC"2 6
```

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jcsm%3Fd%5C+zjC%220%C2%A8eC%222+6&input=B&debug=1)

21 bytes

```
t::." \"o½MËñ"\!bNw
```

[Try this!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=t%3A%3A.%22+%5C%22%02o%C2%BD%C2%82M%C3%8B%C3%B1%22%5C%21bNw&input=A&debug=0)

Also 21 bytes:

```
:jbct." \" ±¢î
"6Nw
```

[Try that!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3Ajbct.%22+%5C%22%01%C2%8B+%C2%B1%C2%A2%C3%AE%0A%226Nw&input=B&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## JS (ES6), <s>64</s> <s>60</s> 52 bytes

```
i=>`  ####
 # # #
###  #
# # #
####`.replace(/#/g,i)
```

Can this be improved:

```
i=>`  ${y=i+i+i+i}
 # # #
###  #
# # #
${y}`.replace(/#/g,i)
```

Comment: `y=i+i+i+i` is shorter than `y=i.repeat(4)`

Comment: ... and `####` is even shorter.

Comment: Actually the whole thing's shorter without templates: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a58gtw3h/)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>90</s> 84 bytes

```c
i;v;f(g){for(i=32;i--;)putchar((v="####*@#@#@#*#@@###*#@#@#@*####@@"[i])&1?g:v-32);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@59pXWadppGuWZ2WX6SRaWtsZJ2pq2utWVBakpyRWKShUWarpAwEWg7KIKil7OAA4oE5DlogGQcHpejMWE01Q/t0qzJdYyNN69r/mXklCrmJmXkamtVcCgVFQG6aBtCSVIiZmpqa1ly1/5UB) Defines a function `f` that takes a character `g`. Too bad encoding the table directly is shorter...

### Old version, 90 bytes

(Still trying to golf this one)

Trying to have only a single `putchar`, but idk. There are unprintables, so here is the hexdump:

```c
λ xxd try-to-make-a-cube.c
00000000: 693b 6a3b 6628 6729 7b63 6861 722a 6b3d  i;j;f(g){char*k=
00000010: 220f 1539 2a3c 223b 666f 7228 693d 303b  "..9*<";for(i=0;
00000020: 693c 353b 7075 7463 6861 7228 3130 292c  i<5;putchar(10),
00000030: 692b 2b29 666f 7228 6a3d 3332 3b6a 3b6a  i++)for(j=32;j;j
00000040: 2f3d 3229 7075 7463 6861 7228 6b5b 695d  /=2)putchar(k[i]
00000050: 266a 3f67 3a33 3229 3b7d                 &j?g:32);}
```

This encodes the cube into a binary lookup table, where a `1` bit represents the input and a `0` bit represents a space. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@59pnWWdppGuWZ2ckViklW2rxC9qqWWjZJ2WX6SRaWtgnWljal1QWgKS1TA00NTJ1NbWBMll2RobAbVm6dsaacLks6MzY9Wy7NOtjI00rWv/Z@aVKOQmZuZpaFZzKRQUAblpGkCrUiGKNTU1rblq/ysDAA)

Comment: Can shave a few bytes off for [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/Tusw6TSNdszotv0gj09bAusxWycFBGQi0HJRBUAvIdABRYC6Ip6wUnamtHWutWVBakpyRWKRRpmZon25VpmtspGld@z8zr0QhNzEzT0OzmkuhoAjITdMA2pAKUaupqWnNVftfGQA).

Comment: The unprintables one can be squeezed to [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOss6TSNdszotv0gj09bUOlNX17qgtKRYQ0lJUxMkmGVrZmKdpW9rZK0JFE/OSCzSULLRshTlV4rOjFXLsk@3MjbStK79n5lXopCbmJmnoVnNpVBQBOSmaQBNToVo0dTUtOaq/a8MAA).

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 217 bytes

```
(((((((((((((((((({}))))<([][]()())>)<(([][])[]{}())>)<(([][]){})>)<([])>)<(((()
())[][]{}()()))>)))<((()()()()()){})>)<(((()()()){}){}()[])>)<(((()()())()){}{}[
])>)<(((()()())){}{}[])((()()()()()){})>))))(([]()()()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY4xDoAgDEUP49I/cAPDRQgDmpgYDYMr4ey1remAlIX//qNhe8pZw3GXi5mmaR0yK6WcMoGAKMESUm59AOJGUz9G5mujnlwFwwr48SfONKs8rBBsTet/7HBeKaOfco954bC/)

Waaaaay too long.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift - 82 bytes + Foundation (18 bytes)?

```
var f={"  ####\n # # #\n###  #\n# # #\n####".replacingOccurrences(of:"#",with:$0)}
```

By default, Xcode-Swift projects have `Whole-Module Optimization`, so that `import Foundation` is not required for this simple lambda-like function. However, running it in online environments requires it, which may add 18 bytes.

**[Check it out!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5920707315c0ca24e9dbb84e)**

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 55 bytes

```
c->"  ####\n # # #\n###  #\n# # #\n####".replace('#',c)
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#hY5BCsIwEEX3PcXHgG1Ac4Gi4AHsxqV1EceogTQtSSqI9Ow1qcWdmIEMf@bz5pOR3mMvtX1lgLZBuaskhSpJ4BCctjdQQXfpQLyM0yGLnw8yaEIFiw1GWm8XAIuvtmCpahsFpv6VbCGc6kzEFznLV8THMqG6/mwiaiY@Wn1BE/MUn9vHEySfwzx9UI1o@yC6uArGFlZQYvEp2G/H7q9jOTuGbBjf)

## Java 7, 77 bytes

```
String c(char c){return"  ####\n # # #\n###  #\n# # #\n####".replace('#',c);}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#hY1BCsIwEEX3PcWnAZuA9AJdeQBXXVoXcQwaSNOSTAQpPXtNtbjU@Yvh8@B9cjpGHKcCiKzZEpaWg/U3kKS7DiA1BcMp@BIQ@ToPsabzueD9v1WUdTCj02RkJao9qWZegDFdXPZu@sdgr@i19fKzczpDq3UeaJ@RTV8PiesxI3Ze0ipSqvnBD3/4buNzMS8v)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `jr`, 12 bytes

```
ðp»2<I∵»τ5$/
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=jr&code=%C3%B0p%C2%BB2%3CI%E2%88%B5%C2%BB%CF%845%24%2F&inputs=%27%26%27&header=&footer=)

```
  »2<I∵»τ    # Decompress the pattern using...
ðp           # Space + input
         5$/ # Split into 5 
             # (j flag) Join by newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 79 bytes

```
+++++[->++++++<<++>],>++..<....<.>>.<.>.<.>.<.>.<<.>...>..<.<.>.>.<.>.<.<.>....
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwSide3AtLaNjba2XawOkKenZ6OnByLs7EAEAoMIPRC2AfNhMhBhvf//lQE)

Not sure why this doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 23 bytes

```
"pjFUC"{i2b(;}%rS+ff=N*
```

I feel like I can still golf this.

```
"pjFUC" e# String literal:          │ "pjFUC"
{       e# For each:                │ 'p
  i     e#   Get code point:        │ 112
  2b    e#   To binary:             │ [1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
  (;    e#   Delete first:          │ [1 1 0 0 0 0]
}%      e# End                      │ [[1 1 0 0 0 0] [1 0 1 0 1 0] [0 0 0 1 1 0] [0 1 0 1 0 1] [0 0 0 0 1 1]]
r       e# Read token:              │ [[1 1 0 0 0 0] [1 0 1 0 1 0] [0 0 0 1 1 0] [0 1 0 1 0 1] [0 0 0 0 1 1]] "&"
S       e# Push space:              │ [[1 1 0 0 0 0] [1 0 1 0 1 0] [0 0 0 1 1 0] [0 1 0 1 0 1] [0 0 0 0 1 1]] "&" " "
+       e# Concatenate:             │ [[1 1 0 0 0 0] [1 0 1 0 1 0] [0 0 0 1 1 0] [0 1 0 1 0 1] [0 0 0 0 1 1]] "& "
ff=     e# Vectorized array lookup: │ ["  &&&&" " & & &" "&&&  &" "& & & " "&&&&  "]
N*      e# Join with newlines       │ "  &&&&
        e#                          │   & & &
        e#                          │  &&&  &
        e#                          │  & & & 
        e#                          │  &&&&  "
e# Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 70 bytes

Encodes the sequence rather directly, with minor optimization:

```
8224PdPdPdPdP10Pd8192+ddPPP10PdPdPdP8224PdP10Pd256*32+ddPPP10PdPdPdPdP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#Mzb9b2FkZBKQAoWGBgEpFoaWRtopKQEBYB4YQtWA@EamZlrG6PIpAf//AwA)

---

Taken to a (not very golfy) extreme, 145 bytes:

```
27065671941896667324298575455432398417474802390765222440949482848513*56759961956005660143530475805610581704254588701249011343446231795984498688+P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#DY2xAQMwCMP@aRcMNpgv@v8zKZu0SKWXE60eLOHt7qlkrjWixMpaE8Oh4zimlZlkLJdO00J9LqDdxqoj1B1gqYIjnyJkTDAvaU8guQEUi@wszOomXLf9/b33Bw)

This computes `A*x+B`, where `A` encodes the positions of the input character and `B` encodes all the rest:

> A = 256<sup>0</sup> + 256<sup>1</sup> + 256<sup>2</sup> + 256<sup>3</sup> + 256<sup>5</sup> + 256<sup>7</sup> + 256<sup>9</sup> + 256<sup>11</sup> + 256<sup>14</sup> + 256<sup>15</sup> + 256<sup>16</sup> + 256<sup>18</sup> + 256<sup>20</sup> + 256<sup>22</sup> + 256<sup>25</sup> + 256<sup>26</sup> + 256<sup>27</sup> + 256<sup>28</sup>
>
> B = 10×256<sup>4</sup> + 32×256<sup>6</sup> + 32×256<sup>8</sup> + 10×256<sup>10</sup> + 32×256<sup>12</sup> + 32×256<sup>13</sup> + 10×256<sup>17</sup> + 32×256<sup>19</sup> + 32×256<sup>21</sup> + 32×256<sup>23</sup> + 10×256<sup>24</sup> + 32×256<sup>29</sup> + 32×256<sup>30</sup>

`P` command prints the resulting number as a byte stream.

Answer (score 0):

## Windows batch, 79 bytes

```
@echo   %1%1%1%1
@echo  %1 %1 %1
@echo %1%1%1  %1
@echo %1 %1 %1
@echo %1%1%1%1
```

Special char. safe, 97 bytes:

```
@echo   ^%1^%1^%1^%1
@echo  ^%1 ^%1 ^%1
@echo ^%1^%1^%1  ^%1
@echo ^%1 ^%1 ^%1
@echo ^%1^%1^%1^%1
```

Comment: Can you use line feeds i.e. `..  %1%1%1%1\n %1 %1 %1...`

Comment: Line feeds are not supported in batch

Comment: I couldn't remember if they was or not and wasn't in a position to test :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused, can you repeat?

Comment: I couldn't remember if you could use them or not and I couldn't test at the time I commented so I left the comment so you would still have the idea

Comment: Line feed on my batch runs well for ECHO

Answer (score 0):

### C#, 53 bytes

```c#
c=>@"  ####
 # # #
###  #
# # #
####".Replace('#',c);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Tcl, 60 bytes

```
proc c x {regsub . $x "  &&&&\n & & &\n&&&  &\n& & &\n&&&&"}
```