# Round away from zero

Tags: code-golf, number

## Round away from zero

Inspired by [Round towards zero](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/190670/52194).

Given a number input via any reasonable method, round the number "away from zero" - positive numbers round up, and negative numbers round down.

If you intend to take the input as a string (via STDIN, for example), you should be able to handle numbers with or without the decimal point. If you take it as a number, it should at least be able to handle floating-point precision (double precision not required) or rational numbers.

You can output a floating-point number with the decimal point (e.g. 42.0) if desired. (Or even have some test cases output floating-point and some output integer, if it makes your answer shorter.)

Standard loopholes are not allowed, etc etc.

### Test cases

```
-99.9 => -100
-33.5 => -34
-7    => -7
-1.1  => -2
0     => 0
2.3   => 3
8     => 8
99.9  => 100
42.0  => 42
-39.0 => -39
```

[Sandbox Link](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18016/52194)

Comment: if we're taking numbers in a string context, such as STDIN, do we need to support the `.0` as the test cases seem to suggest?

Comment: @JoKing yes-- I will update the question to clarify. This was actually the original case, but then people in the sandbox suggested adding non-decimal test cases so uh, here we are with both, sorry

Comment: Feels good to be inspirational :)

Comment: It's funny that all the languages that did so well on the previous challenge by taking integer input and integer output won't work so well, since they can't tell the difference between `-0.1` and `0.1`

Answer (score 17):

## Excel, 13 bytes

```
=ROUNDUP(A1,)
```

#### Alternative

```
=EVEN(A1*2)/2
```

Comment: `EVEN`, what a strange function..

Comment: @tsh I think you mean "odd function".

Comment: @negativeseven Username checks out. :-P

Answer (score 10):

## R, 32 bytes

```
x=scan()
sign(x)*ceiling(abs(x))
```

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzgzPU@jwka3ODkxT0NTUys5NTMnMy9dIzGpWKNCU/O/rqWlniWXrrGxnimXrjmXrqGeIZcBl5GeMZcFF0jqPwA) -- very nice answer!

Comment: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/X6PCtjg5MU9DU1NVX9VQW6PCzkCtQlXVUPO/rqWlniWXrrGxnimXrjmXrqGeIZcBl5GeMZcFF0jqPwA "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ĊṠ¡Ḟ
```

A monadic Link accepting a number which yields an integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9I18OdCw4tfLhj3v///3WNjfVMAQ)** Or see a [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9I18OdCw4tfLhj3v/D7Y@a1vz/H61raalnqaOga2ysZwqkzIHYUM9QR8FAR8FIz1hHwUJHAaQiFgA).

#### How?

```
ĊṠ¡Ḟ - Link: number, N
  ¡  - repeat...
 Ṡ   - ...number of times: sign of N (repeating -1 is the same as 0 times)
Ċ    - ...action: ceiling
   Ḟ - floor (that)
```

Comment: So how exactly does `¡` work for negative numbers? I don't think it's documented

Comment: It's not documented on Jelly's wiki, but `¡`s repetitive nature is implemented with a `for index in range(repetitions)` loop in the code. `range([stop=]-1)` is empty since `start` defaults to `0` and `step` defaults to `1` and "For a positive step, the contents of a range `r` are determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` and `r[i] < stop`." [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range)

Comment: `¡`'s behavior relies on that of Python's `range`, and `range(-1).__iter__().__next__()` immediately throws `StopIteration`.

Answer (score 6):

## Vim, 36 bytes/keystrokes

```
:s/-/-<Space>
:g/\..*[1-9]/norm <C-v><C-a>lD
:s/<Space><cr>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/36pYX1dfV4HLKl0/Rk9PK9pQ1zJWPy@/KFdBjDHHhQsorcD1/7@uoYGBniUA) or [Verify all Test Cases!](https://tio.run/##K/v/30q1WF9XX1eByypdP0ZPTyvaUNcyVj8vvyhXQYwxx4ULJK/w/7@upaWeJZeusbGeKZeuOZeuoZ4hlwGXkZ4xlwUXSAoA)

Explanation:

```
:s/             " Replace...
   -            "   A dash
    /-<Space>   "   With a dash and a space

:g/                             " On Every line matching this regex...
   \.                           "   A dot
     .*                         "   Followed By anything
       [1-9]                    "   Followed by a digit other than 0
            /norm               " Run the following keystrokes...
                  <C-v><C-a>    "   Increment the number by 1
                                "   This also conveniently places our cursor just before the dot
                            l   "   Move one character right
                             D  "   Delete everything after the cursor

:s/             " Replace...
   <Space>      "   A space
                "   (With nothing)
```

Comment: Using `$F-a <esc>` instead of the first line and a macro with `/` as a conditional in place of `:g` and `:norm` gives 29 bytes https://tio.run/##HczBCoJAFEZhWva/QpuLCNbizoxalBXRInqJMpjGCYVwmkx7/Ilcn49z110drKkdJSE@s6ZZ7L28istNlThNfN8f/baThJAcDL5187T0trqiZkeVw1S610cOciBD/KD9fFxFcRMtiFtUrrWBU5WBi0IU4DwXK/AanIoUCpnIscEyEwpj/8sf

Answer (score 6):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 18 bytes

```java
d->d.setScale(0,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBBT4QwEIXv/IoJCUlroIFFo@y6ezDGmyeOxkMXChZLIXTAbAy/HYHdAB6avq8zffPagnfcK9LvQZZ11SAUI7OS4xe7O1jbsxalYlmrE5SVnoqJ4sbAO5cafi2Auj0rmYBBjuPWVTKFcqyRGBup849P4E1u6NwK8HbzeX6R@atIZMmVu8oTZHAcUu@UMiMwTrgSxHd9Ohzmy4sjCoMGjjdPANuLIhbZ7oJhyB42@LjRAQtW8le5Y@EKT6v873y/Y/52TjTiTP01YlY1pOPNnHB/zUmXmPHFoChZ1SKrx5dgRmwn8M0eHONo253bXcgYr2t1IVr8wPo1ZCpSSq9jemta/fAH)

### Explanations

Uses a `BigDecimal` as input and output. `BigDecimal` has a method [`setScale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int,int)) that sets the scale of the number. The first parameter is the number of digits after the dot separator, the second is the rounding mode. `ROUND_UP` is the "away-from-zero" rounding and has a value of `0` so I hardcode that value.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
AĊ×Ṡ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/xSNfh6Q93Lvh/dM/h9kdNa9z//9e1tNSz1FHQNTbWMwVS5kBsqGeoo2Cgo2CkZ6yjYKGjAFIBAA)

This ports [recursive](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191248/66833)'s Stax answer into Jelly, so check that answer out for an explanation.

-1 byte thanks to [Nick Kennedy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42248/nick-kennedy)

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
ĊḞ>?0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9I18Md8@zsDf4f3XO4/VHTGvf//3UtLfUsdRR0jY31TIGUORAb6hnqKBjoKBjpGesoWOgogFQAAA)

-1 byte thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)

### How this one works

```
ĊḞ>?0 - Monadic link. Takes a float, x, as argument

   ?  - If:
  > 0 -   x > 0
      - Then:
Ċ     -   ceil(x)
      - Else:
 Ḟ    -   floor(x)
```

Comment: `ĊḞ>?0` would work as your 6 does.

Comment: `AĊ×Ṡ` is 4 and functionally identical to your first answer.

Comment: @NickKennedy and Jonathan, thanks for the suggestions, they've been edited in

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 23 bytes

```python
lambda i:i-i%(1|-(i>0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoMwEEbhfU/xb4oJTIJpEJugnqQbSwkO6CjipqhnT@3i8W3e8t2GWXxO7SuP/fT@9ODIhu/KHUZxV2qd07xCwAITgg0E472tLuorZx2hJDysJzwJ/yPesKwsm0rFLrGpTrQd9qREn4XOPw)

*-1 byte thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)*

Comment: You can do `(1|-(i>0))` to save a byte off `(1,-1)[i>0]`.

Comment: @xnor Nice find, thanks!

Comment: Well done. I had it at 62 bytes ಥ_ಥ: `g=lambda r:0if r==0 else(int(r)+r/abs(r)if r/int(r)!=1 else r)`

Comment: What is the '|' before the '-'?

Comment: @William bitwise or.

Comment: Yeah, really nice solution. I got stuck at `lambda i:i//1+(i>0<i-i//1)` with 26 bytes

Comment: `lambda i:i//1+(i%-1<0<i)` 24.. wow, I guess it is unbeatable

Comment: @jaaq I really like that solution too! My initial approach was also 24 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 20 bytes

```javascript
n=>n%1?n<0?~-n:-~n:n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc/BCoJAEMbxe08xl0APM@46ha5oPouYRiGzkuHRV98K1oI5//jz8T26tVv6531@ofjrEMYmSHORo22lNu2GUuEmlYTey@KngSZ/S8YEnSOXppBlgNaYg1JmOkflk8YCACIW2izZ3XJlBn6d3suJd2JF5b8qFX0vRPpcCG8)

#### Commented

```javascript
n =>        // n = input
  n % 1 ?   // if n is not an integer:
    n < 0 ? //   if n is negative:
      ~-n   //     return -(floor(-n) + 1) = -floor(-n) - 1
    :       //   else:
      -~n   //     return -(-(floor(n) + 1)) = floor(n) + 1
  :         // else:
    n       //   return n unchanged
```

Comment: I was writing an answer for my 16-byte answer (`n=>(~~n-n%1)%1+n`) until I found out that my code didn't work for numbers between -1 and 1. You might be able to figure out how to make this work with the last 3 bytes there's left!

Answer (score 4):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
1µ-i:'-A{*+'.A@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/9/w0FbdTCt1XcdqLW11PUeH//91jYwt9QwB)

"Adds" (away from zero) 0.999999 and floors the result. `µ` is the closest thing to an infinitesimal in language's operators. With a properly functioning `Trunc(x)` command, answer now supports `0` as input.

Comment: @JoKing Oof. Good catch. It's doing a `divide by input` to get the "sign" of the input value, which of course, divides by 0 when the input is 0. There's no (good) way around that right now. Will need [this commit](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/commit/220e5b9dadb226f8cc711b69431cedf3662dbd9b) first. I'll poke Dennis (side benefit, the answer will get shorter).

Comment: @JoKing Answer now handles `0` correctly.

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
å├╪∙Bß
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=86c3d8f942e1&i=-99.9%0A-33.5%0A-7.0%0A-1.1%0A0.0%0A2.3%0A8.0%0A99.9%0A&a=1&m=2)

#### Procedure:

1. Absolute value
2. Ceiling
3. Multiply by original sign

Comment: The tool I'm using says this is 14 bytes

Comment: Your tool is probably not aware of the [stax character encoding](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax).  If you're still not convinced, in the "Tools" section, there's a download link, where you can actually download the source file and inspect its size for yourself.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 6 bytes

```
**>.@|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/tbTs9Bxq/mtypSZn5CvEGxoYKNgqpCnEW1rqWULEjMAChnqGCgoKUFUQoXiwGETI1MAQLGZqYKBnAlNlYQJRZ2RhrGcKVwhVhzANxAarMzX4DwA)

Just a 1 character change from [my answer on the cousin question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190684/15469).

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (Visual C# Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>41 bytes</s><s>27 bytes</s>24 bytes

```cs
s=>(int)s+Math.Sign(s%1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU@xasMwEJ19X3FLQaKyiOOW1rjOUujUQCFDh5BBqJIjcGWqu6SU4G93VZOh0713vPfunqXSkp1PFGKPux9i99nCf6ZfQ/xqwQ6GCN/gAgWx4WDxPIYP3JoQURCnbNgf0KSeJBRZVFzdL6don/wwGlYYIm/QYzdTtxGZSLrdGj7qXeijoJtKzi3A2SRkR4wdRveNi3V/uJRNoxuvsKxrfe9V@ZBhpau8WSlc6zqDR4VX0d1arxZtk@eUQ/2YnLFHsYTnP5YL8q/M8xhpHJx@T4FdruqEFyxlCxNAMcE0/wI)

First post here, had fun with it, hope u like it.
Kinda felt C# place is empty here

-14 tnx to @expired data
-3 tnx to @night2

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer! Hope you enjoy Code Golf!

Comment: [27 bytes...](https://tio.run/##TU@xasMwEJ19X3FLQaKyiOOW1rjOUujUQCFDh5BBqJIjcGWqu6SU4G93VZOh0713vPfunqXSkp1PFGKPux9i99nCf6ZfQ/xqwQ6GCN/gAgWx4WDxPIYP3JoQURCnbNgf0KSeJBRZVFzdL6don/wwGlYYIm/QYzdTtxGZSEG33dbwUe9CHwXdVFLOLcDZJGRHjB1G942Le3@4lE2jG6@wrGt971X5kGGlq7xZKVzrOoNHhVfR3VqvFm2T55RD/ZicsUexhOdXlgvyr8/zGGkcnH5PgV1u64QXLGULE0AxwTT/Ag "C# (Visual C# Compiler) – Try It Online") Probably still a few to save

Comment: @Expired, yea nice, this kind of coding was so weird at first glance that looks like I forgot about whole library thing, mind to post it as an answer

Comment: Nah just update your answer and use <s> for strikethrough to reduce the bytes :)

Comment: @expired data, tnx, now c# can be in competition too :)

Comment: I don't think that you needed the += assignment and parentheses, this seems to work too: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##TU@xasMwEJ19X3FLQaKyiOOW1rjOUujUQCFDh5BBqJIjcGWqu6SU4G93VZOh0713vPfunqXSkp1PFGKPux9i99nCf6ZfQ/xqwQ6GCN/gAgWx4WDxPIYP3JoQURCnbNgf0KSeJBRZVFzdL6don/wwGlYYIm/QYzdTtxGZSLrdGj7qXeijoJtKzi3A2SRkR4wdRveNi3V/uJRNoxuvsKxrfe9V@ZBhpau8WSlc6zqDR4VX0d1arxZtk@eUQ/2YnLFHsYTnP5YL8q/M8xhpHJx@T4FdruqEFyxlCxNAMcE0/wI "C# (Visual C# Compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: You also need to update your "Try it online!" link in your answer. Instead of typing the whole answer, you can use TIO's export options. In "tio.run", after you are finished with your code, just click on the link icon on top (), then copy the "Code Golf submission (Stack Exchange)" section here.

Comment: @Night2, tnx for the comment, I didnt type the whole answer, I used the `Code golf submission` functionality, Just added a bit of my own words to the end, but for edit I just changed that code line, and u r right there, i forgot to update the link, which brings us back to the first step, to only modify once, kinda SOLID here, anyway, tnx for the hint too

Comment: You've edited your TIO link to the 24 byte version, but the code line itself is still the 27 byte version.

Answer (score 3):

### C, <s>94</s> <s>43</s> 39 bytes

thanks to ceilingcat for 39 bytes

```
#define f(n)(int)(n>0?ceil(n):floor(n))
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##PY3NCsIwEIRfpVSEBEzIn7RR0BfxUtKkBNKtVG/iqxtjknqZ@XZnhzVkMibG3WidB9s4BBh5eGIEF3Y11oe0OLmwLGsCHFPUzIMHhF/3NQ0OtfuxIZyxG/xAquJdMZGtZDJrn3W7V6LWdHtIv4nWVONMUtJjoY6yApzyDKwuBJXZ@zr/y0psFakT4fM7fowLw/SIJMxf)

Comment: [48](https://tio.run/##PY7RCsIwDEV/pQyEBNfatZOtDvFHfJnTSkCjzPk0/PZZ282X3HNvciGdvHbdNHngnNDfHu0guBn7y/DuGWgPxAMySj7Qmjbt6QWEO2o@U8jFvSUGHJ99MB6y1VnIQusj/8CWSaskJkra2TjrOJf70sw1l@XCg3ROOYxkrdomqpROUKgigp4Do2zUevb/cmmWinWBMPz9BQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
*±¹⌈a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8b/WoY2Hdj7q6Uj8//9/tK6lpZ6ljq6xsZ6pjq65jq6hnqGOgY6RnrGOhQ5YysRIzwAob6lnEAsA) Just takes the sign of the input times the ceiling of its absolute value.

Comment: Alternative 5-byter: ```?⌊⌈<0```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 38 bytes

```
\.0+
.
\b9+\..
0$&
T`9d`d`.9*\..
\..*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYoxCoAwEAT7fYdYJNxyMYjePyxTRImFjYX4/zMWw8Awz/le9@5eqBFEOSwWEjqM2Kq12iot/KUT4C5mNEjOnCELVSGJmqBUTMxYu//lAw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\.0+
.
```

Delete zeroes after the decimal point, to ensure that the number is not an integer; the next two matches fail if there are no digits after the decimal point.

```
\b9+\..
0$&
```

If the integer part is all `9`s, prefix a `0` to allow the increment to overflow.

```
T`9d`d`.9*\..
```

Increment the integer part of the number.

```
\..*
```

Delete the fractional part of the number.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 18 bytes

```perl6
{$_-.abs%-1*.sign}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxJDoJAEEX3dYpaqDhQlR5U6AVchBCDkTYkCKZ7YYjx7C2D/tX7b/GetWvP4THgxmIW3qsLcXX1a5J79s29@wRfDWi3By5EuYsxwihGLlSJtnfYNl3t85xfvbv5QMawwSxHkkIAac2n@ekjUILjppMASZYLKxD48wIU6wU1pH@bwpyccEx@AQ)

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                }  # Anonymous block
    .abs  # Absolute value
        %-1  # Modulo -1
           *.sign  # Multiply by sign
 $_-  # Subtract from original
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÄîI.±*
```

A 5-byter should definitely be possible..

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cMvhdZ56hzZq/f@va2mpZwQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/wy2H11XqHdqo9V/nf7SupaWepY6usbGeqY6uuY6uoZ6hjoGOkZ6xjoUOWMrESM8AKG@pZxALAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ä       # The absolute value of the (implicit) input,
 î      # ceiled
     *  # And then multiplied by
   .±   # the signum
  I     # of the input
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 18 bytes

```
Sign@#⌈Abs@#⌉&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PzgzPc9B@VFPh2NSMYjuVPsfUJSZVxKtrGuX5qAcq6bvUM2la2mpZ6nDpWtsrGcKpMyB2FDPUIfLQIfLSM9Yh8tChwuiwsRIzwCkzlLPgKv2PwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 30 bytes

```php
<?=0^$argn-=0<=>fmod($argn,1);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt7WIE4lsSg9T9fWwMbWLi03P0UDzNcx1LT@n5qcka@gFJOnZP1f19JSz5JL19hYz5RL15xL11DPkMuAy0jPmMuCCyxlYqRnAJS31DP4l19QkpmfV/xf1w0A)

If number is not integer, based on the sign -1 (for negative decimals) or 1 (for positive decimals) is added to it and then integer part of the new number is printed.

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 32 bytes

```php
<?=[ceil,floor][$argn<0]($argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42Ojk1M0cnLSc/vyg2WiWxKD3PxiBWA8zQtP6fmpyRr6AUk6dk/V/X0lLPkkvX2FjPlEvXnEvXUM@Qy4DLSM@Yy4ILLGVipGcAlLfUM/iXX1CSmZ9X/F/XDQA)

Basically outputs `floor` of input if it is less than 0, else `ceil` of it.

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 34 bytes

```php
<?=($argn>0?:-1)*ceil(abs($argn));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WQyWxKD3PzsDeStdQUys5NTNHIzGpGCKqqWn9PzU5I19BKSZPyfq/rqWlniWXrrGxnimXrjmXrqGeIZcBl5GeMZcFF1jKxEjPAChvqWfwL7@gJDM/r/i/rhsA)

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 5 bytes

```
‼σ±ü*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9Rw57zzYc2Ht6j9f@/rqWlniWXrrGxnimXrjmXrqGeIZcBl5GeMZcFF1jKxEjPAChvqWcAAA)

### Explanation

It's nice to find usage for the `‼` operator.

```
‼       apply next two operators to (implicit) input
 σ      sign (-1, 0, or 1)
  ±     absolute value
   ü    ceiling of that absolute value
    *   multiply the rounded absolute value with the sign
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
⌋₁ℤ₁|⌉₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/1FP96OmxkctS4BkzaOeTiD1/390vKWlnqVOvLGxnqlOvLlOvKGeoY6BjpGesY6FDljKACgQDyRiAQ)

or `⌉₁ℕ₁|⌋₁`.

```
⌋₁         The input rounded down
  ℤ₁       is an integer less than -1
    |      and the output, or, the input
     ⌉₁    rounded up is the output.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pF/\./`, 35 bytes

```perl
$_&&=$F[0]+($_!=int&&$_*(@F-1)/abs)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXk3NVsUt2iBWW0MlXtE2M69ETU0lXkvDwU3XUFM/MalY8/9/Yz0DLl0TPVMuAyDD4l9@QUlmfl7xf92cAjf9GD19AA)

Comment: fails `3.0`.  For switches, `-pF\.` is sufficient: the `//` are optional.

Comment: also `0.0` is true

Comment: Fixed both of those.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 57 bytes

```
: f ( x -- x ) [ signum ] [ abs ceiling ] bi * >integer ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYw9D4IwFEV3fsUd1aQNHxotJK6GhcU4GQeopTZCIaUk@utrU4jLeee@5N625nYw7nYtq0uOtzBadOhr@wqg7ay5VYOeMBph7Xc0SlsUUVnl4MNTEDl0rcvRYoMPCPHY4o5JST33eHitmwlcqE5p6XOjsMPZbwgpDApHGKPMt2lEsowesOhxvQlNgsSBKc2W/ynw39ynNF4n2GLuBw)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 15 bytes

```apl
{⍎'⌈⌊'[0>⍵],⍕⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/6sf9fapP@rpeNTTpR5tYPeod2uszqPeqUC69n8aUAVQGqK4q/nQeuNHbROBvOAgZyAZ4uEZ/P9R76pqdc@8gtISKwV1oMatOuoK/qUlUH4ayJhDKw6tt7TUs1QA6jfWMwVS5kBsqGeoYKBgpGesYKEAljUx0jMAKbHUMwAA)

Simple Dfn. Uses `⎕IO←0`.

#### How:

```apl
{⍎'⌈⌊'[0>⍵],⍕⍵} ⍝ Main function, argument ⍵.
            ⍕⍵  ⍝ Stringified argument
           ,    ⍝ Appended to
      [0>⍵]     ⍝ This item... (0 if ⍵ is positive or 0, else 1)
  '⌈⌊'          ⍝ of this string (which are the functions Ceiling and Floor, respectively)
 ⍎              ⍝ Executed as APL code.
```

Answer (score 1):

## sed, 131 bytes + 2 bytes for `-r` flag

```
/^-?[^.]*(\.0*)?$/bQ
s/^(-?)9/\109/
s/([0-8]9*)\..*$/_\1/
h
s/.*_//
y/0123456789/1234567890/
G
s/(.*)\n(.*)_(.*)/\2\1/
:Q
s/\..*$//
```

### Ungolfed

```
#!/bin/sed -rf

# identify integers
/^-?[^.]*(\.0*)?$/ b isInt

# add a leading 0 if we'll need it later
s/^(-?)9/\109/

# convert to format: -?[0-9]_[0-8]9*
s/([0-8]9*)\..*$/_\1/

# move the part that will remain constant into the hold buffer
h
s/.*_//

# [0-8]9* can be incremented via character substitution
y/0123456789/1234567890/

# reassemble parts
G
s/(.*)\n(.*)_(.*)/\2\1/

:isInt
# Get rid of anything after the decimal point
s/\..*$//
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (node.js), <s>30</s> <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```js
s=>~~s+Math.sign(s%1)
```

Inspired by the C# answer.

Thanks to @Value Ink and @Gust van de Wal for -7 bytes!

Thanks again, @Gust van de Wal for another -2 bytes!

Comment: Why use `+=` when `+` will do the trick in this case? -1 byte

Comment: Instead of `parseInt()`, I'd just use `~~` at the start or another bitwise operator like `|0` or `^0` at the end to save another chunk of bytes

Comment: @ValueInk wow, I have no idea why I wrote `+=`, thx for pointing it out

Comment: You can still drop the the outer parentheses

Comment: @GustvandeWal oh, I didn't know that! thanks

Comment: `Math.sign(s%1)` => `s%1?s>0||-1:0`?

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>54</s> 48 bytes

```powershell
$a,$u=$args-split'\.'
(1,-1)[2*!+$u+($a-lt0)]+$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5dT4MwFIav119xJNWBtA1QzEYMCYnx2sV5NxfD8MyPMEFaosnkt2NHWWbsTd@nPe/T1tUXNuoVy5IXVYM93ab7nuaMtinNmxfFVV2@6emjmBI3ZDz0VtHlmU9b36U5L3XgrX2a9x0hmUtY5vIkEQkDHgaBN7CU4sqwjC3OTJ7ZGIrQQDRAwMDOR0IykEOcM5gPwSqPRieOROAwiG3T4TIZ2Owe8eAHzmFPJvSj3W2wYUDxu8ZC4zOkQJ@uzU2Dqi21wQu6hXHOnK8Wy5tW6Wp3t3k3hTVkRjNZtkWBSh3KY4/j50lqJpwHVBqKXKFzmLI@Av/W/fHRUWOKt38@dvJ1pCP9Lw)

Thanks [@mazzy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80745/mazzy) for the improved golfing !

### Original implementation

```powershell
$a,$u="$args"|% s*t '.'
(((1,-1)[$a-lt0]+$a),$a)[!+$u]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3RSsMwFIavm6c4hsy1LgltU9mKFAritYN5N4p09UyRzs4mQWHrs9esnbqLkP87Od@fffOFrX7DuhZV02LPttmhZyVnNqOsbF81PU5A3xiYyinxfT/iIgrWrBS1CYsZKwPuzvpqxmzRd4TkPuG5L9JUphxEFIbBwErJW8cqGXHu8nyMkYwcxAOEHMb9WCoOaogLDoshjJW/jTSJZUg5JKNJhUoHdndAAjjCBA7EYx92t8GWA8PvPVYGXyAD9nznXlrUtjYOr9kWzntuvl6u7q02ze5x8@6EAnJX461sVaHWJ/nsCfz8L3WeR59QG6hKjfS09lfoPVz8fCF0pCP9Dw)

### Explanations

```powershell
$a,$u="$args"|% s*t '.'        # splits the input as a string using '.'
                        [!+$u] # if there are no decimals
(                   ,$a)       # return the int part as is
 ((1,-1)[$a-lt0]+$a)           # return the int part + or - one depending of the sign of the input
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5dT4MwFIav119xJNWBtA1QzEYMCYnx2sV5NxfD8MyPMEFaosnkt2NHWWbsTd@nPe/T1tUXNuoVy5IXVYM93ab7nuaMtinNmxfFVV2@6emjmBI3ZDz0VtHlmU9b36U5L3XgrX2a9x0hmUtY5vIkEQkDHgaBN7CU4sqwjC3OTJ7ZGIrQQDRAwMDOR0IykEOcM5gPwSqPRieOROAwiG3T4TIZ2Owe8eAHzmFPJvSj3W2wYUDxu8ZC4zOkQJ@uzU2Dqi21wQu6hXHOnK8Wy5tW6Wp3t3k3hTVkRjNZtkWBSh3KY4/j50lqJpwHVBqKXKFzmLI@Av/W/fHRUWOKt38@dvJ1pCP9Lw "PowerShell Core – Try It Online") ?

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>45</s> <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```powershell
[int]("$args"-replace'\.0*[^0]','.9')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1dT4MwFIav6a84aaqAKU2hmI2LJST@AI3zjqFh9cyPsIEUosnkt2PHR7zq@6Tv@5y6@sbGvGNZBrpqcGCHzXnIPk5t7lFWNG@GBg3WZaHR3Ql5kz3L3OWuSFx/6AlJPcJTL0gSkXAIQin9kZUSt5ZVPOHK5tUUQxFaiEaQHKZ@JBQHNcY1h/UYJuVipHEkJOUQT0saqGRk@/rEh1@4gjNx2Kk77rHhwPCnRt3iK2yAvdiPBk1Xtpau2QHmGnGyh@1dZ9rqeL//tPUcUitxtp3WaMxlOs8C/PpX2gZ9QtOCLgzSS2vROY/LlXlInJ70ZPgD)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 17 bytes

Save 6 bytes thanks to the awesome comments of [MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)!

```julia
x->x+sign(x%=1)-x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYrLCsIwEEV/5VIqzOAkNAbRLNIvcSP0wYiMpSrk72NcXM7hcB/fp95DqUuuxY3l@NbVqBxyYNfia4dCDeRS8kngYvTnhktb8EEwCE4@Cq6C/4Ox7Wof6npSRh7R09KMb9YxZpvqDw)

An alternative with 22 bytes

```julia
x->sign(x)ceil(abs(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYrBCsIwEAV/5VF62IVNMAbRHNov8VK1kZWyllYhfx/jYZg5zOu76BRKzUMtbtz1aVT4PutC021vyTW/NyjUQC4lnwQuRn9qOjeCD4KD4Oij4CL4H4x1U/tQ15MyhhE95VZ8tY4x26P@AA)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know the `%=` that can be very useful in codegolf

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `r`, <s><sup>5</sup></s> 4 bytes

*Built-ins I previously didn't know existed FTW!*

```
ȧ⌈∆±
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=%C8%A7%E2%8C%88%E2%88%86%C2%B1&inputs=-33.5&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
      # Implicit input
ȧ     # Absolute value
 ⌈    # Ceiling
  ∆±  # Change to the sign of input
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), 20 bytes

```
_?{0-1?{0/_?{1+_0+0+1?{0+_0+0+_0+0+_0+0
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyJfP3swLTE_ezBcbi9cbl8_ezErXzArMFxuK1xuMT97MCtfMCswXG4rXG5fMCswK18wKzAiLCJbWy0zMzUsMTBdXSIsMF0)

Takes a pair representing a rational number.

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 43 bytes

```java
a->{return(int)((int)a/a<1?a>0?a+1:a-1:a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pdG9DoIwEAfw3ae4sY2h8qFRROUJdHE0DidUU8RCSjExhGfH0@joUoc2Tf73u2tyBd7Rq2qpi/w6ZCU2DWxR6W4EoLSV5oyZhF1HbzAsr9pTKQF50lPeWLQqgx1oWMOA3qYz0rZGMyrm7H3jBFdBihs/xXGwRI8O2SEhXVMr0p8m90rlcKPBbG@N0pfDEfnrDwD7R2PlTVStFTUlttRMC8O8OBYx58mvmt/JW0eRmLnruTsNROCMfWcZisjZLpzlXyuahsL/Y7/xV/ejfngC)

Comment: The lambda function can be written without using an explicit `return` statement.

Comment: @Joel is indeed right. And you can save 4 additional bytes changing the `(int)a/a<1` to `a%1!=0`: [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##jZDBCoJAEIbvPcV0CHaJXTSLMtGeIC8eo8OkW6zpKroFET67TVDXtsPAwPf9/MyUeEfRtMqUxXXMK@x72KM2zwmANlZ1Z8wVpE/aoWNFcztVCpBHA/HeotU5pGAghhFFwsjiDGf@NPZ2mNDM/S0KGj5GFGgpTYFP7t7oAmrqYpnttLkcjsjftQDZo7eqls3NypaIrQwzsmMiDGXIefTTCQK5cjlrl@BL36F4Dr6QgcPYOPgfxy4X0nP@I/w6w2QYXw)

Comment: There's also the `BigDecimal.setScale` method that gives excellent results, like [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191293/16236) demonstrates

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##pdG9DoIwEAfw3ae4sY2hUtBoRfEJdHE0DidUU4VCoJIYw7Nj/RpZynSX/O93N9wVG/SKUupreuuSDOsatqj0cwSgtJHVGRMJu6ftoSJpcT9lEpBGrc1rg0YlsAMNa@jQi4mdojgm3zrBFd9g7G/40uNLn3aRNaVdYM2PNoVKIbfnyN5USl8OR6TvywD7R21kzoq7YaVNTKaJZhXxhGCC0qhvpj/56DBkM3c9d6eccWfsO8uAhc524SwHvWgaMH/Af8Vft6O2ewE "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 19 bytes

```perl6
{$_+|0+.sign*?/\./}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzBDoIwEETv@xV7MEZpdttSFXpAfqSJMREMCaChJ4J8ey2gc5i8N4d5V0N7Cd2I@xqLMO1u4qME@@bZJ6V0LOdQvwY8tE1f@SNOgOjvI9YoOumodA/hOHYiYQ5kLVssrkhaKSBj@LyaOQFlGLNIBqRZb5yCwt@uIGWzoYH8v@awXi4YL78)

Not the shortest solution, but I'm working on it. Basically this truncates the number, then adds one away from zero if the number was not whole to begin with

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Î*Ua c
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=zipVYSBj&input=LTEuMQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 46 bytes

```
func[n][(pick[0 1]n = t: to 0 n)*(sign? n)+ t]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcxBDoIwEEbhPaf4l4hxMqUYLYnxDm6broCaxmQkUM5fXQ26@97mLdNYHtPoQxX7EjcZvARfz2l4eYYJghtyj/wGQw5Nvaan3L86IocyL0kyIk7Okau0rKXzXpedhowGq1qy6qvqb9m1xD9/R1w@)

The slightly more readable version is 2 byte longer (those long function names!):

```
func[n][to 1(sign? n)* round/ceiling absolute n]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 16 bytes

```scala
_.setScale(0,UP)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1dC4IwGIXv9yt2uUG9@FGUgkHRrRCJVxGxdNpCp8wVRPjbbXVjq7vzPBzO6TJWsUHUbaM07t4ANdMX2IhyyzNRswr2zU3mQpZxk3M4oeZ85ZnGMRMSP1HOC1ybSJgqQ7xWij0OiVamfqQhTqXQODK1O6twEZJxNVqNmUbDCTquE3PPiTNJd3RAqDUjupKkINMggIDSb@P7MLfNwkYXXEs4FnngW7y06O9u5oHz8x98DOr74QU)

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 22 bytes

```scala
x=>x.signum*x.abs.ceil
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY09C8IwFEX3/Io3NoKPfiiaQgqCq5M4iUNa0xJJU0lTqYi/PRZdjE73ncPj3r4SWviuvMjKwU4oAw9yljW00xkJ2@SwsVbcj3tnlWlONIeDUQ749HYTGuo82nZDqSUvPkmB@5EXI/aqMUM7G1GUPVZSaU/Idepw2kR1NGcMGaXfJstwGZpViAkmgYgDSjELeB3Q39wixfhnn70NeT79Cw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/), <s>43</s> <s>36</s> 35 bytes

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclBCoMwEEDR/ZxiFlmoZcIkaWlj03oQUSgkoCAKteDg5VPbzV/8t69D3oZxSvhOr4jTOKc7xgXW9EEiVL@R5aEMhBBUq9pCeiYpq8o@uZFTIYEbMrUpa@l67nJc5gSZvNceyDl9AboCGW2AwWoHN/jT2Wo@3B/9Ag)</s> <s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclBCoMwEEDR/ZxiClkoZYaJabGxEQ9SKhQSUBCFKjj08qnt5i/@@6xD3odxSvhOr4jTOKc7xgXWtCERmt/I2hoLIQTzKLSXU6udngsN0pFtbNlo2cszx2VOkMl79kDO8RWoBrJsQaBiBzf406ViOdwf/QI)</s> [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcnBCsIwDIDhe54ihx42JKFZFddZ2YOIA6GBDcYGTjD48nV6@Q//99nG8h6nWfGpj4zztOgF8wqbvpAI3W8UuzqBlJK7VTZ4st4OlSXfk3RSd1YP/l7yuigUipEjUAh8AjoDCQt4aDhAC386Nux3j3u/)

Using nested ternaries, for extra confusion. XOR logic from the [round to 0 solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190756/15940).

```bash
x=$1
<<<$[(x^0-x?x+(x<0?-1:1):x)^0]
```

Explanation:

```bash
x=$1                                    #set x
         x^0-x?                         #if x has decimals (shorter than x^0!=x)
                                        #(0 is falsy in this context) 
                    x+(x<0?-1:1)        #  if x<0 subtract 1 else add 1
                                :x      #otherwise the result is just x
<<<$[(                            )^0]  #truncate to int & output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 5 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
××⌈∘|
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=Ozz98PRHPR2POmbUAAA&f=S1Mw1DPlSlM4tN5MzxwA&i=AwA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

A train submission which takes a number on the right. Uses [recursive's idea.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191248/80214)

Answer (score 0):

## MMIX, 16 bytes (4 instrs)

```
40000002 17000200 17000300 F8010000
```

## Disassembly / Explanation

```
rfz BN   $0,0F              // if negative, skip next instruction
    FINT $0,ROUND_UP,$0     // round to integer towards +inf
0H  FINT $0,ROUND_DOWN,$0   // round to -inf, no effect if already rounded
    POP  1,0                // return
```