# Find the nth digit of Euler's number

Tags: code-golf, math

## Challenge

Given a positive integer `n`, you must calculate the nth digit of \$e\$, where \$e\$ is Euler's number (2.71828...).

The format of the output can be a number or a string (e.g., `3` or `'3'`)

### Example

```
# e = 2.71828...

nthDigit(3) => 8
nthDigit(1) => 7
nthDigit(4) => 2
```

Shortest code wins.

Comment: Language like "You cannot use any external libraries or constants" is [not up to our standards of clarity](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13775/56656) on this site.  The best way to fix this problem is to remove the restriction, since it doesn't do anything good for your challenge in the first place.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip! I will keep that in mind for future questions. I would remove the restriction, but the purpose was so that people can't just say something like `str(np.e)[:index+1]`, which would be too easy.

Comment: @applemonkey496 It doesn't solve the challenge anyway because a floating-point number doesn't have infinite precision (the output can't be right after 15 digits or so).

Comment: Is there an upper bound on \$n\$ for this challenge?

Comment: Even with arbitrary precision, it's not straightforward to get the `n`-th digit, because it may have been rounded up. For example, `e` with 4-decimal precision would give you `2.7183`, but actually the 4-th decimal is `2`, not `3`

Comment: How I would exploit the rules: `push 0, implicit output`. Outputs any digit of *e* rounded to the thousands.

Comment: @Wezl  What language is that?

Comment: @MitchellSpector It would probably work for 05AB1E for 1 byte but it's just pseudocode.

Comment: @Bubbler, good point. I removed the constraint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žtsè
```

Pretty convenient builtin ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L6S4sMr/v83BgA) or [verify the first ten digits](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R/i6mevpPCobZKCkr3f/6P7SooPr/iv8x8A) or [output the infinite list of digits](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L6S//8B).

**Explanation:**

```python
žt    # Push the infinite list of decimal value of e (including leading 2)
  sè  # And 0-based index the input-integer into it
      # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>34</s> 32 bytes

*Solution provided by @l4m2*
*-2 bytes thanks to @xnor*

```python
lambda n:`(100**n+1)**100**n`[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKkHD0MBASytP21BTSwvCTIjOi/2fll@kkKmQmadQlJiXnqphrGnFpVBQlJlXopGmkamp@R8A)

Very,  very slow.

[Verification](https://tio.run/##dZRda@NWEIbv/StOHQpx4sKZ831SXGgpXXLR3nQLhRA2SiwnYrOSkWXW@@vTZxw3uxetcYJkzXm/ZjTbL9PT0LuXl99//vvDr9fvrt//aVYmWjv75fodV2IvLr4@ms3OzEPz/LB/bqbWTE@teW43k/k07Caz7h67aWeGjTlcXJzruX6xpH4a9/2Dlh9Mt9F/OzMNg3luxsd2acZh36/NfmuG0ayHz71pdma3bR@6TdeuOd0PR6JmOqEeYdHF3SvJuesXi9m63Zhmux2Hw/lh2S/HxdXMbID8YLreHMamf2zPe/1RD67EcqFifsLkFZpWlE3nd4e7m6uvZm8X5tKMMzO2034EZXZk6aeno9NXuLMTa/dJHT4Pn9vRNEdDW67u1dzM7ASCu5O8VwuXsnQX/fK35nnXLmDlh1sK3f8Vvh/339Sdqfj7YXp6ZdiZ5vFxbMlpMP2pDzMtUeIVqFcnCzu5@UHPt7BqFqef/xj69uXMbLqRNkJr/8VoV3OXpbiifyFWG6Lz0SfrSg5ZfHQpuVBzjtmFbKtPtdZYYw41pZpycpkHNqfkLediyLGGyMHiJJfooqQUXNYvJVWqd9Z6G2t1UiQHGABy8HoYKs98cBVWSiKY2RfxzrsCUQ0@VKi4B76WYnP0UpXESrUikWofpOTKQeskBluqhFp9KCVIytFWF0JOEpJNqdjiXArFWkklZMRIiR6tPsQQXPBZlAFKnoHibKoxCsggFF/AcEm8x2yIxZNqjs5SqfJSJMOaqcngiNrW@IjVViEN0MkzZOdBTQTseIoPZFZXfCo4crDhrSTiTp4SEXH0p9RcEBhtRJDXNmRL2KqR9iSCSiUFTFRS1DQkAVgqXPb1nq75RIM0I9qLN0In2SiBTMgl1VIj3dKUcFigLSVVXwuNDwlVsahiMCu9IF9gMekTsiruRLK3glap2SZNX4L1XEstPqOR4lTIw3EXtAvad44Vq@1GGjgcDjEWiUDlmLKoaqVBnkZhccsYFSpouUbHEHJd@Kh62mKzYyoSXSix1OCAxiwuMIhR7GFEx5n5SmIDSvGIgeTJnGmpiC9Zu@kxRzx0DU8MJDoYWCcJGVbfGoaY/BnAwNQlj2EkeNEZ5kmwMZCOF4ZEZVNr0UnrmL9MFgSrQ0cxbeOtDLwA2kMsW0aDCcGUZcSZYx155p2pRQ0vcC2ITyUDUlOMThxpwUfXYyYUvmGuu31q2QC6N3W1d@yX4yLQnd7O9Ofum3Wqi0JX4Jqd9bYUu8Vx8ax1y@tauTLbkdVq5r1ZzZemW87/6j/27Pnlfy9LCHeN7rL5j@Z@bJuPuqyOgN@tTHvT3b4BXvcPwzi2D9MR1qyXZn4zv6Tkqrv0t5fz2/lRSWe@Z6XpGrRvR1fHz@u50w23L/8A) up to \$166\$ digits. The idea for this verification comes from @l4m2: calculates \$x^{100^n}\$ by calculating `x=x**10` repeatedly (\$2n\$ times), each time truncating \$x\$ to a few left most digits (the TIO link uses \$500\$ digits). By changing the truncation to round down or up, we obtain the lower and upper bound for the result. If the lower and upper bound agree to \$n\$ leftmost digits, we know that the exact calculation will also result in those \$n\$ digits.

I have verified that this solution works up to \$n = 333\$, using `MAX_DIGITS = 1000`.

**How**

This solution uses the following well known approximation of \$e\$:
$$ e = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^{x}$$
Substituting \$x = 100^n\$, we have:
$$ e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{100^n} \right)^{100^n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left(100^n + 1 \right)^{100^n}}{\left(100^n\right)^{100^n}}$$
Since the denominator is a power of \$10\$, we can ignore it entirely.

According to [this analysis on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3381351), the worst case error of this approximation is:
$$ \Delta < \frac{3}{x} = \frac{3}{100^n}$$
which means roughly that every time \$n\$ increases by \$1\$, we gains 2 digits of precision.

Comment: [Is yur code or my optimize wrong?](https://tio.run/##LYxBDsIgEEX3nGKWM5VGYNmkPQN7NSlGUJI6bbALOD2K6fLl/fe3sr9WNtWOi3vfHw6yLIPFfNaq64yShSAGyFNDrRT45eMBf4OGsvT678t0mExChPFajzMeZost5ZOWTPOFe32rYU0QITIkx0@PWhpFg4AtRd4xYCSqXw)

Comment: @l4m2 My solution is wrong unfortunately :( At first I thought your optimization slightly lowered the result due to truncation, e.g `...90...` becomes `...89...`, but even if I round up after each division, the result is still wrong. Even though my solution's error goes down by a factor of `10` every time `n` increases, the error can still be large enough to push patterns like `...200...` down to `...199...`.

Comment: So can [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKkHD0MBASytP21BTSwvK1kyIzov9n5ZfpJCpkJmnUJSYl56qYaBjrGnFpVBQlJlXopGmkamp@R8A) be wrong? (though it's much slower it's same length)

Comment: @l4m2 I have tested it to 133 digits, and there doesn't seems to be a problem. The worst case error is \$3 / 100^{n}\$, which means that as n increases by 1, your answer gains 2 digits of precision (compare to 1 digit in in my answer). It seems rather unlikely that such small error can influence `n` previous digits, it would require a really long string of small digits like `9000...`. No guarantee though.

Comment: @l4m2 May I include your solution in my answer?

Comment: My link's for such purpose

Comment: Python's exponentiation actually right-associates so you can cut those parens.

Answer (score 4):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 66 bytes

```
I?dF+k^1sF2sE2sN[q]sR[1lNlF*dsF/d0=RlE+sElN1+sNlLx]dsLx+lE*0k1/I%p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/TPsVNOzvOsNjNqNjVqNgvujC2OCjaMMcvx00rpdhNP8XANijHVbvYNcfPULvYL8enIjal2KdCO8dVyyDbUN9TteD/f1MA)

[Or print more than 800 digits before TIO times out after a minute.](https://tio.run/##RY7LCoMwFET3fsUltGANonHro6sEBEnBrViwRiuYJtbbhYv@eyql0M0MHDjD3DqcXN@9oFhWe1@7B2QZ4RdBXHlWgs5XhiJBnqBsni3WDdNSi0ChiFSc15pT5FoyilJXW6uw2qjmQTyzqDwubt/xvNGu4Psmj9PUUHo6eQDK7gEw9JOF0AA5GMgLIH@4EwJvUD2EI/yOfT0z7OU@)

I've verified these 800 digits against the published value at a [NASA web page with 2 million digits of e](https://apod.nasa.gov/htmltest/gifcity/e.2mil).

(It may be possible to shorten the code a bit by keeping some of the variables on the stack and accessing them via stack manipulation instead of using dc's registers.)

**Explanation**

```
I     # 10.
?     # Input value.
d     # Push on stack for later.
F+k   # Add 15 and make that the number of decimal places to calculate.
^     # 10 ^ input value, saved on stack for use at end.
1sF   # 1!, stored in F.
2sE   # 2 is starting value for e.
2sN   # for (N=2; ... )
[q]sR # Macro R will be used to end loop.
[     # Start loop L.
  1         # Push 1 for later.
  lNlF*dsF  # F = N! and push on stack.
  /d        # 1 / N!, duplicate on stack
  0=R       # If 1/N! == 0 (to the number of decimal places being computed), end loop.
  lE+sE     # Otherwise e += 1/N!
  lN1+sN    # N++
  lLx       # Go back to start of loop L
]dsLx  # End macro, save it in L, and execute it.
+      # Get rid of extra 0 on stack.
lE     # e, computed with sufficient accuracy 
*      # Multiply by 10^input value, which was saved on the stack early on.
0k1/   # Truncate to integer.
I%    # Mod by 10 to get desired digit.
p     # Print digit.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>146</s> 105 bytes

```python
n=int(input())
N=n+3
q=2
e=[1]*N
exec('q=i=0;exec("q,e[i]=divmod(10*e[i]+q,N-i+1);i+=1;"*N);'*n)
print(q)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc0xDoMwDEDR3cdgIU6oFJcx8hVyAcQEkeqhJq7Sqj19Ktj@m379tcehc@/Kos2J1ndziJBZwwzGdyi80OozlG/Z3GgsHNPVg01lkZV3@TyP3VH0J4NN@SaBMElgSoPPmEavCPV1Dgx7pxj/) (thanks to @SurculoseSputum)

This only uses small integers to calculate digits of \$e\$.  With a modification to use a lazy upper bound for `N`, it uses the algorithm described in

> A. H. J. Sale. "The calculation of \$e\$ to many significant digits." The Computer Journal, Volume 11, Issue 2, August 1968, Pages 229–230, https://doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/11.2.229

Essentially, the idea is that \$e\$ can be written in "base-factorial" as \$1.11111\dots\$, where digit \$n\$ has place value \$1/n!\$.  The algorithm repeatedly multiplies this number by 10 to extract digits one at a time.  In fact, if one were to record each value of `q` in the outer `for` loop, the result would be the first `n` digits of \$e\$.

One complexity is that we need to know how many digits in base-factorial to calculate.  In this version, \$n+3\$ is (more than) sufficient.  A previous version of this answer used an estimate from Taylor's theorem, and it looked for a value of `N` such that \$N!\geq 10^{n}\$, doing so by calculating all factorials until it exceeds this power of ten.

Comment: +1 for this spigot algorithm (these algorithms are nice -- they produce one digit at a time as they run).  I did a version in dc based on an algorithm similar to this one; unfortunately it came out to be longer than the dc answer that i posted earlier.  (I golfed it down to 101 bytes, which isn't even close to the 66 bytes in the answer I posted.)

Comment: [119 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY47DoMwEET7PcXKDWCIhCkhewVfAFEQMGElsmBEfqd3cLqZYua97XvMq1RhWEeHhEqpIMSyPY80A0sTGXjPvDicrqbUWmqbk2kmTRY8VeCoNZ224D5uUJ6YyibGxBeu5Y5Gfj3WMT2Xsea@sBfOTdZwPEm0bZQW2HaWA3042QDTuqMgC@693N25LLMa8C906i394zb2NQpgxGC0Dj8) by replacing the loops with `exec "..loop.."*n`, and changing from a function to a program.

Comment: If you accept a larger value of `N` (aka `N=n+3`), then this can be shorten to [95 bytes](https://tio.run/##FccxCoUwDADQPacQF7VVaPxjyRV6AXHSghmMzaeKnr7i9l568nbIWIoQSzpz20EgsT9QGiHShLMJEO@41EpMzn9stI8Tz7TytR9ri858tdqHgS12ni2hb0zwtRFIf5ZcaSno3As).

Comment: @SurculoseSputum Thanks! I modified it to be Python 3 compatible, which loses 10 bytes to your 95.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
°D>smI<è
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0AYXu@JcT5vDK/7/NwIA)

Very, very slow.

Answer (score 2):

## [SageMath](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/index.html), <sup><s>35</s></sup> 33 bytes

```sagemath
lambda n:str(N(e,digits=n+9))[-9]
```

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLs81JzE1KSVTIsyouKdLw00jVSclMzywpts3TttTUjNa1jOVKyy9SyFTIzFPQMNYx1DHRMTQAAU0rLgUgKCjKzCvRSFOqzqxV0LVTqE7TyNSsVdIEAJFLGOc=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Very, very *fast!*

Comment: Fastest gun or fastest code?

Comment: @Λ̸̸  You've got to ask yourself one question: "Do I feel lucky?" Well, do ya, punk? :P

Comment: You're lucky because you answered the question *just before* the question is closed.

Comment: @Λ̸̸ Oh wow! I *am* the lucky one today! :D

Comment: @Λ̸̸ That's nothing; I can still answer questions *after* they're closed!

Comment: @Neil So can I, I just can't post them! T_T

Comment: @Neil I have the feeling I'm missing something obvious here, but how did you do that? Question is indeed closed 3 hours ago and your answer is from 2 hours ago. Did you became a moderator/admin? ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I blame client-side validation.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>98</s> <s>100</s> <s>72</s>, 71 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,p=1,q=1,k=1:k<n+9and f(n,p*k+1,q*k,k+1)or str(p*100**n/q)[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZTNbtswEITvfgoCudiKgfJXJIP4SYoeXKRuDbeK4/qSp3eX366NghDFvx3OzK50/rz@el/i7XbY/d7/@f62d8v2vAvbD3lOu/Byel2e@355c4e1bEynZ9maTlt5b94v7u/1sj5PwftpWr58bL4u325PLrrqVk8uuCbD9nhnV1x3nnd0SfrkZpmPvSqrVU4m9mZpUVa6rFVZqcyqnO3EdFrhqZybWZ1lNnO9Rnjms8R4u6@AMyIzsePGwS7IuHF3kfGIyeDce0XpsjcYRMHzoBaYRDQGTqqGbhpUbzIN3eISuN20elOiPCuMArckvFFFHZwMRuVsBKmB1KR5lCU43pV4ZqMPcBjnEywbmHqjR0HBsYbKjK5xspG5gLeFDAxnMxwCzni0NmIjijIzT1TjrDoT8DiZr4kcZMaZ1fDQoCo1LpvHnhwXdCln5dBQpTwiKwkXktVcQ6U37EhGMurUvRnvPT5Ww6nGJzyyfa8@rVaPS9H4JatfTx@5T@uxWy1qrOZD3ewgJRzSHEXTpnlr8NLaS4YSaNG@nwZ6MwcLdaQOpcfXUGHezOdunHSvg93Il2aiWy3eayNw90wNdNPl/99fHeQfcHTHxV32y88f6@L95sWdL8flKv@L42a7uv0D)

-1 byte, remove unneccesary whitespace.

#### older answer

```python
f=lambda n,p=1,q=1,k=1:k<n+9and f(n,p*k+1,q*k,k+1) or str(p*100**n/q)[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZTNbtswEITvfgoCudiKgfJXJIP4SYoeXKRuDbeK4/qSp3eX366NghDFvx3OzK50/rz@el/i7XbY/d7/@f62d8v2vAvbD3lOu/Byel2e@355c4e1bEynZ9maTlt5b9z7xf29XtbnKXg/TcuXj83X5dvtyUVX3erJBddk2B7v7IrrzvOOLkmf3CzzsVdltcrJxN4sLcpKl7UqK5VZlbOdmE4rPJVzM6uzzGau1wjPfJYYb/cVcEZkJnbcONgFGTfuLjIeMRmce68oXfYGgyh4HtQCk4jGwEnV0E2D6k2moVtcArebVm9KlGeFUeCWhDeqqIOTwaicjSA1kJo0j7IEx7sSz2z0AQ7jfIJlA1Nv9CgoONZQmdE1TjYyF/C2kIHhbIZDwBmP1kZsRFFm5olqnFVnAh4n8zWRg8w4sxoeGlSlxmXz2JPjgi7lrBwaqpRHZCXhQrKaa6j0hh3JSEadujfjvcfHajjV@IRHtu/Vp9XqcSkav2T16@kj92k9dqtFjdV8qJsdpIRDmqNo2jRvDV5ae8lQAi3a99NAb@ZgoY7UofT4GirMm/ncjZPudbAb@dJMdKvFe20E7p6pgW66/P/7q4P8A47uuLjLfvn5Y12837y48@W4XOWHcdxsV7d/)

-28 bytes simpler formula

Simpler algorithm based on more usual formula:

$$e = 1 + \frac 1 {1!} + \frac 1 {2!} + \frac 1 {3!} + \frac 1 {4!} + \cdots$$

But re-expressed as sequence of approximations:

$$1, 1+1, \frac{(2(1+1)+1)}2, \frac{(3(2(1+1)+1)+1)}{(3\cdot2)}, \frac{(4(3(2(1+1)+1)+1)+1)}{(4\cdot(3\cdot2))},...$$

These can be expressed as ratio of recurrence relations $\frac {p_k}, where

$$p_0 = q_0 = 1 \\
p_{k+1} = kp_k + 1, q_{k+1} = kq_k, \: \forall k \ge 1$$

#### old answer

```python
f=lambda n,p=3,q=1,r=19,s=7,b=10,x=1,y=0:x-y and f(n,r,s,r*b+p,s*b+q,b+4,p*100**n//q,x) or str(x)[n]
```

+2 bytes because I mistakenly omitted `f=`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYzNDsIgEAZfZY@FfqbgT0yb8CTGA6RWSXRLlx7o0yOXSWYOk479s/K51sV9/S/MnhjJXbA5C3F2RHZ3BGcNSiuHM1M5HeR5pqVjCDJEhz4hN24I/RVJW2O05mHYUBStQnmXrqgHP@vSLFJkEs/vV3czRk2UJPLedlGh/gE)

This approach is based on continued fractions. Not happy with it yet, but it seems good for a few hundred digits.

Based on the continued fraction:

$$e = 3 - \cfrac 2 {7 + \cfrac 1 {10 + \cfrac 1 {14 + \cfrac 1 {18 + \cfrac 1 {22 + \ddots}}}}}$$

Computed by the recurrence relation:

$$\frac {p_0} {q_0} = \frac 3 1 , \: \frac {p_1} {q_1} = \frac {19} 7 \\
\frac {p_{k+1}} {q_{k+1}} = \frac {p_k (4k+2) + p_{k-1}} {q_k (4k+2) + q_{k-1}}, \: \forall k \ge 1$$

which was arrived at after a first reading of [An Essay on Continued Fractions](https://www.math.kth.se/optsyst/forskning/forskarutbildning/SF3881/Euler.pdf) by Leonard Euler.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
⁵*³
¢‘µ*¢ŒṘḣ³Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//4oG1KsKzCsKi4oCYwrUqwqLFkuG5mOG4o8Kz4bmq////Mw)

A monadic link taking a single integer, plus a niladic helper link.

### Explained

```
⁵*³
¢‘µ*¢ŒṘḣ³Ṫ

Link f:
    *(10, input) # 10 * input

Main Link:
    tail(head(str(*(Increment(f()), f())), input)) # str((f() + 1) * (f()))[:input][-1]
```

Comment: Do you mean 2-indexing? Since the question requires the digits after the decimal point.

Comment: @Λ̸̸ Well, whatever it is, it's the same as the other answers

Comment: Here's how to do the same thing in [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R41atRw0ztFRcHu7udvj//78xAA).

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>30</s> 12 bytes

```
Ｐ←×ψ⁺²Ｎ¤≕EＴ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@3NKcks6AoM69Ew8onNa1ERyEkMze1WKNSRyEgp7RYw0hHwTOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQxMIrLncMnNyNNxTS8ISizITk3JSNZRclUDiIUWZuRqGmtb//1v@1y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Inspired by @ASCII-only's comment and his answer to [Bake a slice of Pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/93615) (compare my answer to [Music with pi and e](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206906)). Explanation:

```
Ｐ←×ψ⁺²Ｎ
```

Input `n` and print `n+2` nulls to the left without moving the cursor, so it remains on the last null.

```
¤≕E
```

Fill the nulls with the expansion of Euler's number.

```
Ｔ¹
```

Trim away everything except the current character.

Previous 30-byte answer calculated the Maclaurin expansion of `100ⁿe` to `n+10` terms:

```
Ｎθ≔Ｘχ⊗θη≔⁰ζＦ⁺χθ«≧⁺ηζ≧÷⊕ιη»§Ｉζθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1BDoIwEEXXcoouS4KJLg0rIpsuMMQbFKjQpEyxnaLBePY6ARMTlzPv/bx2kK610sQoYAp4CWOjHL@neVJ4r3vgtX3Q43jIWGlDY1RHMM3Y8DMILXTdrGO8NsGvMknslewqOW3WVfcDrpi22@AfCsBSz7pTGRPQOjUqQMrpb@2d1E4D8gIFdOrJz9IjX9I1lcd4ivvZfAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔Ｘχ⊗θη
```

Start with a term of `100ⁿ`.

```
≔⁰ζ
```

Initialise the total to `0`.

```
Ｆ⁺χθ«
```

Repeat `n+10` times.

```
≧⁺ηζ
```

Add the current term to the total.

```
≧÷⊕ιη
```

Divide the term by the number of loop iterations.

```
»§Ｉζθ
```

Print the `n`th digit of the total.

Comment: or of course, [the cheaty way](https://tio.run/##RcwxC8IwEIbhv1Iy3UEdHItThyJZMroUh2vyoUIaJVyK//7M5vq88Man1PiWbDarLwlfmlMi58ZhOSQ3UdykvmTLIBe6rlfoXxbH4@BLrNhRFIl8@TQNbd9QifnOPQc8@oXOzBezabLTkX8)

Comment: @ASCII-only Ah, so I guess you can get Pi that way without Fill()ing it too? Although, it turns out that using `Fill` is still shorter anyway, so...

Comment: yeah, this is just the direct translation of mathematica's `N[E, whatever + 1]`

Comment: @ASCII-only Ah, because for *Music with pi and e* I did wonder how to get the relevant number of digits, since just trying to stringify `GetVariable("E")` fails and I didn't know about `N[]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 21 bytes

```
Floor[E 10^#]~Mod~10&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2r73y0nP78o2lXB0CBOObbONz@lztBA7X9AUWZeiYNjUVFiZXSqTrWhgYFBbex/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Whispers v3](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 52 bytes

```
> Input
> eᵢ
>> ≻1
>> 2ᶠ3
>> 4ⁿ1
>> Output 5
```

[Try it on repl.it!](https://repl.it/join/wpjvvcdd-razetime)

Run with `python3 whispers\ v3.py euler.wisp < input.txt 2> /dev/null`

Input is the first line in input.txt.

Euler digits builtin ftw!

Answer (score 0):

## bc -l, 37 bytes

```
scale=s=read();(e(1)*A^s+scale=0)%A/1
```

[Try test cases online!](https://tio.run/##RY0xCsIwAEX3nOITFBKlbepqUuigqzcQ0jRaoSYlqZN49hhaxOUt731@p@OQjJ7RTMHfg35CSnq6nGmKRo9WRRWs7hk/Mstqvmuvcb8KwbdtVaecEnLzAQ83veZMvEVZHsSHAL3PAKwZPAoHulkb1YAuojMoRpTV/1n@IrrMnU1f)

Input on stdin, output on stdout.