# Music with pi and e

Tags: code-golf, math, number, music, pi

Because I forgot to celebrate Pi Day (14.3), let's celebrate with \$\pi\$, \$e\$ (Euler's number) and music!

### Challenge

No,  we don't have time to eat a pi-pizza, let's make a program.
What you need is \$500\$ digits of \$\pi\$, and \$10\$ digits of \$e\$.

The input is an integer \$n\$ between \$0\$ and \$499\$ inclusive.

Then you should loop through the first \$n\$ digits of \$\pi\$:

If the digit is:

- \$0\$ then the note is `C`
- \$1\$ then the note is `D`
- \$2\$ then the note is `E`
- \$3\$ then the note is `F`
- \$4\$ then the note is `G`
- \$5\$ then the note is `A`
- \$6\$ then the note is `B`
- \$7\$ then the note is `C'`
- \$8\$ then the note is `D'`
- \$9\$ then the note is `E'`

Next, for each digit in \$\pi\$, take a digit from \$e\$ based on this mapping:

- If the digit from \$\pi\$ is \$0\$, take the \$1\$st digit from \$e\$
- If the digit from \$\pi\$ is \$1\$, take the \$2\$st digit from \$e\$
- If the digit from \$\pi\$ is \$2\$, take the \$3\$st digit from \$e\$
- etc.

You need only \$10\$ digits of \$e\$, because the digits in \$\pi\$ are between \$0\$ and \$9\$.

Finally, take the note and the digit from \$e\$. Return a tuple (or equivalent) containing:

- the note
- the \$e\$ digit divided by \$4\$ (representing the beat)

### Test cases

```
In:10
Out:
('D', 0.25)
('G', 2.0)
('D', 0.25)
('A', 0.25)
("E'", 1.0)
('E', 2.0)
('B', 2.0)
('A', 0.25)
('F', 0.5)
('A', 0.25)
In:5
Out:
('D', 0.25)
('G', 2.0)
('D', 0.25)
('A', 0.25)
("E'", 1.0)
```

#### Help

Here are \$500\$ digits of \$\pi\$:

```
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196442881097566593344612847564823378678316527120190914564856692346034861045432664821339360726024914127372458700660631558817488152092096282925409171536436789259036001133053054882046652138414695194151160943305727036575959195309218611738193261179310511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912
```

And \$10\$ digits of \$e\$:

```
2.7182818284
```

Note that '3.' and '2.' don't count in the digits of \$\pi\$ and \$e\$, and that we are using \$0\$ indexing (so the \$0\$th digit of \$\pi\$ is \$1\$ etc.).

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer wins.
- Optional; After every tuple or list output, there can be a trailing newline.

#### As one week is over, here is an ungolfed code in Python 2:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 526 bytes

```python
def music_maker(n):
 i=p=1;x=3*100**n
 while x:x=x*i/-~i/4;i+=2;p+=x/i
 pi_number=str(p)[:-1] #First 3 lines calculates Calculate Pi
 euler='7182818284'
 del x,i,p #You don't need those Variables any more. They were ment for calculating
 for i in range(n):
  current_pi = pi_number[i] #Current Pi
  current_e = euler[int(current_pi)] #Current e
  number_to_note = {0:"C", 1:"D",2:"E",3:"F",4:"G",5:"A",6:"B",7:"C'",8:"D'",9:"E'"} #Dict number to note
  print((number_to_note[int(current_pi)], int(current_e)/4)) #Prints result
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZJPT8JAEMXv/RQvy6EUV6GAikt6UBSvHoyJIaapZZSJ7bbZbmOJ0a@OW/APxsNmJ7O/9@ZNsuXargo93GyW9IS8rjiN8@SFTFcHygNHZRROm2jUCweDXk97eF1xRmhUEzU97h9@cH885YNoOC0PoqbPHkqOdZ0/kokqa7plsFCH4QM6czaVxQgZa6qQJllaZ4l15ey7xI1TU505pX8aToaT9ox9D0vK0EiWJTr3RY1loX0LTbSEi14R7hLDyWPmvBK9Rl4YOsLtitZ4JUPISVs8FeZnJutnb9tgsIZJ9DPtlkVaG@PouGREv3ss2MWf7Z62GX84ctg28IK17f6qgz0BOX7nE9si1oVtRW8DJWZCIlTiUsihEldCjpSYCzlW4lrIYyXOhTxR4kLIU4f6Qk4c6q4zx/riHZ1LTu2XMWyB1thNKk2bpPt34L90EvsdCvrjIEDnptVWMFTVmd3sf4VwEHhbZ2@/exxsPgE)

Comment: Here's a dict:`{0:"C", 1:"D",2:"E",3:"F",4:"G",5:"A",6:"B",7:"C'",8:"D'",9:"E'"}`

Comment: Great, it looks ok now, so I've upvoted and deleted my comment. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks. I didn't get replies for those 2 mistakes in the sandbox.

Comment: Made Euler's number lower case, feel free to revert my edit if you don't like it.

Comment: @Noodle9 Thanks for the edit!

Comment: I've edited the question to try to improve the formatting, as well as try to make it slightly clearer, as it came up for review in the Close Votes queue. If you don't like the changes I've made, please feel free to [rollback](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/206906/revisions), or edit it yourself

Comment: What is C'? Is that a sharp?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thank you very for the edit. It looks awesome and mathematically like now.

Comment: @mbomb007 No, it's not; it's C one octave higher. C♯ is C sharp.

Comment: @mbomb007  See [Helmholtz pitch notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_pitch_notation) on Wikipedia.  `C` is an octave below middle C.  `C'` is middle C.

Comment: Need clarification: you say that this is to use 0 based indexing, so an input of 0 would result in 1 note output, but your examples use 1 based indexing (input of 10 yields 10 results), so which is it?

Comment: @Xcali Then it's also the same. If input pi-digit is 0 then your note is C... And if your pi-digit is 0 take the 1 e-digits...

Comment: Will we be able to hear what it looks like?

Comment: @Kaddath I tried in Python 3 to play Music, but it didn't work. Can anybody do this?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Normally, after how much Time shall I declare a winner for this question?

Comment: @Tanmay for `code-golf` it's not ogligatory to declare a winner, as there are multiple languages that obviously cannot compete in length (while still pretty interesting to golf), but if you want to accept one, usually it's recommended to wait at least a week. But don't forget to upvote any number of answers you think deserve it!

Comment: @Tanmay That's not the question.  The question is, when the input is 0, how many notes do I output?  When the input is 4, how many notes do I output?

Comment: "Xcali When the input is 0, output 1 note. When input is 4 output 5 notes. This will just make 2 or 3 bytes longer(in a ""normal"" language)

Comment: @Kaddath Edit to your comment: Will we able to hear what it _hears_ like? ;D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>33</s> 30 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LεAuS7£ÀÀD3£''««žsyè©èžt¦®è4/‚
```

Outputs as a list of pairs in the `["string-note", beat-decimal]` format.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP9vc2FiaWX//0zOtUF1UzfCo8OAw4BEM8KjJyfCq8Krxb5zecOowqnDqMW@dMKmwq7DqDQv4oCa//8xMA)

**Explanation:**

```python
L                # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
 ε               # Map each integer to:
  Au             #  Push the uppercase alphabet
    S            #  Convert it to a list of characters
     7£          #  Only leave the first 7: ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]
       ÀÀ        #  Rotate it twice towards the left: ["C","D","E","F","G","A","B"]
         D       #  Duplicate it
          3£     #  Only leave the first 3 character of this copy: ["C","D","E"]
            ''«  #  Append a "'" to each: ["C'","D'","E'"]
               « #  Merge the two lists together:
                 #   ["C","D","E","F","G","A","B","C'","D'","E'"]
  žs             #  Push an infinite list of pi-digits: [3,1,4,1,5,...]
    yè           #  Index the current integer into it (0-based, so leading 3 is skipped)
      ©          #  Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
       è         #  Index this pi-digit into the notes string-list
  žt             #  Push an infinite list of e-digits: [2,7,1,8,2,...]
    ¦            #  Remove the leading 2
     ®           #  Push the pi-digit from variable `®`
      è          #  Index it into the infinite list of decimal e-digits
       4/        #  Divide it by 4
  ‚              #  Pair the pi-note and e-digit/4 together
                 # (after which the resulting list of pairs is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 10):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>150 ... 134</s>  133 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @KevinCruijssen*

Expects a BigInt as input and prints the music to STDOUT. This also works for \$n>500\$.

```javascript
n=>{for(k=p=1n,x=3n*100n**n;x;p+=x/k)x=x*k++/k++/4n;for(;x<n;)console.log('CDEFGABCDE'[d=(p+'')[x++]]+" '"[d/7|0]+'7182818284'[d]/4)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY1LCsIwFACvIt3k89S0WmghPsH/IUoXpR/RlpfQigTUs8dmMcxmYJ7Vu5rq8WFfKzJN6zv0hPtPZ0beo8WElg63JJM4JilJO20BneqFQyd7ABVISYdeux1pURuazNCuB3Pn7HS@XG@H4yxWNMgtMCYKB1CWEC1YVDQq@8YlsCzJN3kgnbtSpeLnOx6ewv8B)

### How?

#### Part 1: compute \$n\$ digits of \$\pi\$

This is based on the following formula:

$$\pi-3=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3}{4^n}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)\times\frac{1}{2n+1}$$

Instead of using floats -- whose precision is obviously far too limited -- we use a Big Integer \$x\$ initialized to \$3\$ times a large enough power of \$10\$ and process integer divisions until we have \$x=0\$.

For 500 digits, we could just use \$x=3\cdot10^{503}\$. We instead start with \$x=3\cdot100^n\$, which is more than enough to get \$n\$ correct digits and easier to golf.

```javascript
for(                    // loop:
  k = p = 1n,           //   start with k = p = 1
  x = 3n * 100n ** n;   //   start with x = 3 * 100 ** n
  x;                    //   stop when x = 0
  p += x / k            //   add x / k to p after each iteration
)                       //
  x =                   //   update x to:
    x * k++ / k++ / 4n  //     x * k / (k + 1) / 4 (and increment k twice)
```

#### Part 2: convert to music notes

```javascript
for(; x < n;)           // repeat as many times as requested:
  console.log(          //   print:
    'CDEFGABCDE'[       //     string of notes
      d = (p + '')[x++] //     d = x-th digit of pi, extracted from p
    ] +                 //
    " '"[d / 7 | 0] +   //     append a quote if d is greater than or equal to 7,
                        //     or a space otherwise
    '7182818284'[d]     //     get the d-th digit of e (using Math.E would be longer)
    / 4                 //     and divide it by 4 for the beat
  )                     //   end of console.log()
```

Comment: -3 bytes by removing `k=0` and reusing `x` in the second part, since it's already `0` after the loop in the first part: [134 bytes](https://tio.run/##FY3JCsIwFEV/RbrJ8NS2WmghPsH5I0oWpYNEyktoRQLqt0ezONzNuZxH82rmdjLuuSLb9WHAQLh/D3biBh3mtPS4JZlnGUlJyivhALlHLw1AGilIpEbFg/I7UqK1NNuxX4/2ztnpfLneDsf/sLpD7oAxUXsArSFZsKTu0vKTaWBlXm2qSPH3dFqIbxh4jIrwAw).

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Mbignum=bpi`, <s>86</s> 84 bytes

```perl
say+(C..G,A..E)[$_],"'"x($_>6),$",((exp 1)=~/./g)[$_+3]/4for(substr bpi<>+1,2)=~/./g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJbw1lPz13HUU/PVTNaJT5WR0ldqUJDJd7OTFNHRUlHQyO1okDBUNO2Tl9PPx2kQts4Vt8kLb9Io7g0qbikSCGpINPGTttQxwiq5v9/43/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA2AdFJmel5pri1QMQA)

### How?

```perl
for               # loop over
  (substr         # a substring of
     bpi<>+1,     #   PI to the appropriate number of decimals
     2)           #   starting after the second character
  =~/./g          # split into characters

    say+              # output
      (C..G,A..E)[$_],  # the note letter
      "'"x($_>6),       # a ' if it is in the next octave higher
      $",               # a space
      ((exp 1)          # Euler's number
       =~/./g)           # split into characters
       [$_+3]            # skipping the first 3 (2.7)
       /4                # divided by 4 beats
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 97 bytes

```
Print[C[D,E,F,G,A,B,"C'","D'","E'"][[#]]|R[E,10,2+#][[1,-1]]/4]&/@#&@@R[Pi,10,#,-1]&
R=RealDigits
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYqxDsIgFAB3PgMSOvhMi6ljE7Sga4MjeQMhrSWxNVE2tb@OsNxwd4uL87i4GLxLU5eGV1ij7a0CDRe4wgnOQPuKAlUFuqJoLUP8GqtBNHDYsSwE7AVi3SKvJeNSGjuEUlnxnJjOjO6hwj3Ed5qk9vMzb9vNu3X7kPyRFsixIb/0Bw)

Prints notes as `[key] | [duration]`, with one note per line.

Since Mathematica's number->string functions are so bulky (`FromCharacterCode`, anyone?), hardcoding the keys' names as symbols seems to be shorter.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 52 bytes

```
Ｐ×φψ¤≕Pi→→≔ＥＫＤＮ→Ｉιθ⎚Ｅθ⁺⁺⁺§…α⁷⁺²ι×'›ι⁶ ∕Ｉ§⪫74×²1828ι⁴
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9Ba8MwDIXv/RVGl8rgwVrKWpZTSVnpICOMsbubao2oa6e2E9ZfnzlZyw67CImn9@mpqrWvnDZ9X7QmcuPZRvzgMwX8UuIqZTZ5YWNwS/FTe9Z7QwglwyAUriN8fudjHf9N6xD4aLHQDZZEpw17qiI7izvbtPGtPe/Jo1TiZlAi1yEiy9Rdkj03pJOeTcox0IC5KFGaNuBfWcedPdA35tfKUF67BrUSS3nbmysx4n6fgSkosfWkY7rLSjzJQQMBqW644wPhmODOfHVsEZYLuAMSDmar@QoG3wheJITM@n722D905gc) Link is to verbose version of code. Actually works up to `n=998`. Explanation:

```
Ｐ×φψ¤≕Pi
```

Charcoal apparently has a built-in for π, but unfortunately the only way I know how to use it is copied from the Charcoal answer to [Bake a slice of Pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/93615/17602) which involves using it as a flood fill. Here I just output `1,000` null characters which therefore gives me `998` decimals of π, well above the `499` required by the challenge.

```
→→≔ＥＫＤＮ→Ｉιθ
```

Now input the number of decimals required, read them from the canvas, and convert them to integers.

```
⎚
```

Clear the canvas ready for the actual output.

```
Ｅθ⁺⁺⁺
```

Map over the digits and concatenate...

```
§…α⁷⁺²ι
```

... the first `7` letters of the uppercase alphabet, cyclically indexed by 2 more than the digit...

```
×'›ι⁶
```

... an `'` if the digit is greater than 6...

... a space...

```
∕Ｉ§⪫74×²1828ι⁴
```

... and the appropriate digit divided by 4, taken from the string `7182818284`, constructed by doubling the string `1828` and inserting it into the string `74`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>173</s> <s>164</s> <s>162</s> <s>156</s> <s>150</s> <s>149</s> <s>143</s> 141 bytes

```python
def f(n):
 i=p=1;x=3*100**n
 while x:x=x*i/-~i/4;i+=2;p+=x/i
 while x<n:i=int(`p`[x]);print"CDEFGAB"[i%7]+"'"[i<8:],1907986849/9**i%9/4.;x+=1
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PY1LCoMwFAD3niIIUk3axlipJvEt@j@ECC6q@KCkoQh93fTqqavuZmBg/Geenq4I4T6MbExdZiKG4EFZgh1Xec65i9h7wsfAyBAQR7n5oiwtCiisF0AS/0HjDAK6Oe1931KXWf9aLD6dL9fb4Ri3mFSdiFcLNLXp1krnla73daml5hwTLcutJQEqjOmyzsIP)

Prints the pairs newline-delimited to STDOUT in the format `string-note beat-decimal` (space-delimited).

Port of [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206909/52210), so make sure to upvote him!
-6 bytes thanks to *@ovs*, which opened up -6 more bytes by switching to Python 2
-1 byte thanks to *@Arnauld*
-2 bytes thanks to *@Tanmay*

Comment: You don't need the second colon in the slice without a step and `1907986849//9**d%9/4` is a little shorter than `int('7182818284'[d])/4`.

Comment: Also reducing the number of assignment expressions doesn't hurt: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY69DoIwGAD3PkVDQuxXNKUCQsEO/j8EYTABpMGUpmKsi6@OOLhccsvlzHvsBh1lxk5T3bS4JRpyhJU0khdORpSHlCZhhPCrU/cGu9xJRxVjq8@MuFCBXBcmkI4xhbBtxqfVJfEOx9P5stt7JalzqfRIHqMlBsq@AvDTKvAWXllvs7xachGmIttksWBMUFr7gsXQDhb3WGlsr/rWzEvVZOwv0xIeAqC/JADTFw "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ovs Thanks! Now that I don't use `:=` as much anymore, it's also shorter in Python 2 with ``int(`p`[k])`` and regular `/` instead of `//`.

Comment: [159 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY5NCoMwGET3niIIxXzaEq2KITaL/h8iZFFQa7DEkFqabnr1VBddzMBj3mLMZ@pHnVNjvW/aDnVYAwuQ4oZnteN5nKVxXKZ5gN69erTIMcddrAjZfOcqapXwbW0S7ghRAbLt9LJa4PB4Ol@u@0MocMO40hN@ThYbEIMEWFUyCaNQNDvKmFwva1RldEuXFJFoJJACutGiASmN7E3f2/mV9MYuboezFCD4Qwngfw)

Comment: @Noodle9 ? Did you forgot to update the page when you made that comment or was there some sort of delay? I'm already at 143 bytes when you made your 159 bytes comment. ;)

Comment: @Tanmay Thanks for the -1 byte (and an additional -1 by removing the space between `print"`). :) But next time please leave a comment with the golfing suggestion instead of editing someone else's answer.

Comment: Guess we were out of sync somehow - did it on my phone. :(

Comment: @Kevin Thanks. I did not know how to do propose a golf.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 29 bytes

```
ƛkAf7Ẏ2Ǔ:3Ẏ\'vJJn∆iin∆i›∆ė4/"
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLGm2tBZjfhuo4yx5M6M+G6jlxcJ3ZKSm7iiIZpaW7iiIZp4oC64oiGxJc0L1wiIiwiIiwiMTAiXQ==) or [Run both test cases!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQaiIsIsabIiwixptrQWY34bqOMseTOjPhuo5cXCd2Skpu4oiGaWlu4oiGaeKAuuKIhsSXNC9cIiIsIjs7WsabYCA9PiBgaiIsIlsxMCw1XSJd)

Port of 05AB1E. If it can't output rationals instead of decimals, add `øḋ` before `"`. Then it will be as strings.

### How?

```
ƛkAf7Ẏ2Ǔ:3Ẏ\'vJJn∆iin∆i›∆ė4/"
ƛ                              # For each item `n` in the (implicit) inclusive one range of the (implicit) input
 kA                            # Push the uppercase alphabet
   f                           # Convert to list of characters
    7Ẏ                         # Leave only the first seven letters: ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]
      2Ǔ                       # Rotate left twice: ["C","D","E","F","G","A","B"]
        :                      # Duplicate
         3Ẏ                    # Leave only the first three letters of the duplicate: ["C","D","E"]
           \'vJ                # Append a single quotation mark to each letter: ["C'","D'","E'"]
               J               # Join these two lists together: ["C","D","E","F","G","A","B","C'","D'","E'"]
                n∆i            # Get the `n`th (zero-indexed) digit of pi
                   i           # Index this into the list of notes
                    n∆i        # Get the `n`th pi digit again
                       ›       # Increment it
                        ∆ė     # Get the zero-indexed E digit from that
                          4/   # Divide by four
                            "  # Pair the pi-note and e-digit/4 together
```

Answer (score 1):

## perl -MMath::BigFloat -pl, 170 bytes

```
$n=$_;$p=new Math::BigFloat;$p->accuracy(500);$_=$p->bpi;s/..//;s!.!'('.substr(CDEFGABCDE,$&,1).("'"x($&>6)).', '.((substr 7182818284,$&,1)/4).")\n"!eg;/(.+\n){$n}/;$_=$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7fCoIwHIVfRWW4jfQ3DS1xKPT/yjcIQkVMkDmcUhG9eivzqovDgY8PzpFV34ZaI5GgC0cyEdXNyPLhGsfbpj62XT58qZvmZTn2efkgoedRji7JBAvZcMUAGOPKBBMTDGos1NCT3f5wPG2233KQ7fgUiIWtO0F2uqIUsGNgIGR2jbUfLaMpweyygIJFz8Iyq5ozAouzoE8kXuw3a2vte@9ODk0nlHaz/6/ale0H)

### How does this work?

```
$n = $_;
```

This gets the input (which is in `$_` due to the `-p` switch; the `-l` switch removes the newline).

```
$p = new Math::BigFloat;
$p -> accuracy (500);
$_ = $p -> bpi;
s/..//;
```

This gets us the 500 required digits from \$\pi\$. First we create a `Math::BigFloat` object, give it an accuracy of 500 (so, 500 decimals behind the comma). We then query the object to get \$\pi\$, which we store in `$_`. And we then remove the first two characters, to set rid of the leading `3.`.

```
s !.!
  '(' .    substr (CDEFGABCDE, $&, 1) . ("'" x ($& > 6)) .
  ', ' . ((substr  7182818284, $&, 1) / 4) .
  ")\n"
  !eg
```

This does the majority of the work. We take each digit of \$\pi\$ and replace it with the result of the middle three lines of code above. During the replacement, the digit being replaced is in `$&`. We start with an opening paren, then we look up the note by using the current digit as in index into a string (`substr (CDEFGABCDE, $&, 1)`. If the digit is greater than 6, we need to add a prime (`("'" x ($& > 6))`). We then add a comma. Then, to get the beat, we index into the digits of \$\epsilon\$, and divide by four (`((substr  7182818284, $&, 1) / 4)`). Finally, we add an closing paren and a newline.

```
/(.+\n){$n}/;
$_ = $&
```

This trims the resulting string to the desired length. We're grabbing `n` times a group of non-newline characters followed by a newline character, and store the result into `$_`, which gets printed due to the `-p` command line switch.