# Print 100 digits of π

Tags: code-golf, math, kolmogorov-complexity, pi

Your challenge is to print any 100 consecutive digits of π. You must give the index at which that subsequence appears. The 3 is not included.

For example, you could print any of the following:

- `1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679` (index 0)
- `8214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196` (index 100)
- `4428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273` (index 200)

Output may be as a string / digit list / etc.

To ensure answers actually produce known digits of pi, all answers must be verifiable through the [Pi API](https://api.pi.delivery/v1/pi?start=1&numberOfDigits=100) (note: This API counts the 3, your answer should not).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84444/find-the-nth-decimal-of-pi)

Comment: Does we need to actually run our code to completion, or can it be really slow?

Comment: But theoretically any sequence of integers eventually occurs in pi at some point...

Comment: @ShiranYuan But that would probably require calculating a googol digits of π to find out where that sequence starts.

Comment: [near-duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/506/calculate-500-digits-of-pi) with the very slight difference that digits ```3```, ```1``` and ```4``` cannot appear in the code...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I'd say this is reasonably different as this allows for _any_ 100 digits of pi, meaning you can take advantage of compression or similar.

Comment: @xnor Yes, as per site rules, it's fine if your code _theoretically_ outputs the digits eventually.

Comment: Does the program needs to output or even comput the index where the sequence starts? Or can I just output 100 zeros provided I have a source somewhere that tells me where exactly in the digits of Pi this occurs for the first time?

Comment: @quarague You need to put the index in your answer, and as the challenge says you have to verify that with the Pi API.

Comment: For what it's worth Pi API is [limited to \$10^{14}\$ digits](https://api.pi.delivery/v1/pi?start=100000000000001&numberOfDigits=100). There are twelve zeros [here](https://api.pi.delivery/v1/pi?start=1755524129973&numberOfDigits=100) but that's probably as good as it's going to get unless you code something up, and prove it is correct in place of using the provided API. cc @quarague

Comment: [Here are some experiments](https://qr.ae/pKTb1Z) on the compression of pi digits (in binary format) by a fellow Intellivision game developer. TLDR: using standard compression algorithms is pointless.

Comment: @ShiranYuan Theoretically it is still unknown if pi is normal :) (https://doi.org/10.1080/10586458.2002.10504704)

Comment: The 3 left of the decimal comma should have index 0, the 1 right after the comma should have index -1 (not 1 but -1). So that the digit value is: `digit * 10**index`. Starting with index -1 doesn't make sense (IMHO).

Comment: So index -1 isn't permitted?

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES11), 53 bytes

Starts at index 0. Returns a BigInt.

```javascript
f=(x=375n*10n**97n,k=3n)=>x?x/k+f(x*k++/k++/4n,k):82n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcndDkAgGADQ1@kHIRa2eJaWMmpfJrPePlycq3OoR0V97eddQlhNzlaiJLnogTQ1EDIKKJzkgOWclsQctSgRRyn7dd/haWgh6wAxeFP5sCGLMM4v)

The underlying formula is:

$$\pi-3=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3}{4^n}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)\times\frac{1}{2n+1}$$

(also used in [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206909/58563) to [this other challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/206906/58563))

Answer (score 9):

## Trivial answers

This is mostly for answers that use a built-in arbitrary-precision pi constant, or a built-in that generates digits of pi.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
from mpmath import*
mp.dps=102
print(str(pi)[3:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1chtyA3sSRDITO3IL@oRIsrt0AvpaDY1tDAiKugKDOvRKO4pEijIFMz2tgqVvP/fwA)

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```python
žs¦т£
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7iQ8suNh1a/P8/AA)

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `H`, 18 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 2.25 bytes

```python
ɾ∆i
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJIPSIsIiIsIsm+4oiGaSIsIiIsIiJd)

#### Explained

```python
ɾ∆i­⁡​‎  # ‎⁡The H flag presets the stack to 100
ɾ    # ‎⁢For each number in the range [1, 100]:
 ∆i  # ‎⁣Push the nth digit of pi, 0 indexed, hence avoiding the `3`
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

## [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m), 12 bytes

```python
ØP%1µ×1ȷ100Ḟ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARcA6P9t///DmFAlMcK1w5cxyLcxMDDhuJ7//w)

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 31 bytes

```python
Print@@@RealDigits[Pi-3,10,100]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxMHBISg1McclMz2zpDg6IFPXWMfQAIgMYv//BwA)

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```python
Ｐ-×φψ¤≕PiＴ¹⁰⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@3NKckM6AoM69Ew0pXRyEkMze1WCNNR6FSU9Oayy0zJ0fDPbUkLLEoMzEpJ1VDKSBTCSQRUpSZq2FoYKBp/f//f92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Starts at the `997`th digit of `π`. Explanation:

```python
Ｐ-×φψ
```

Make space for `1999` characters in the canvas.

```python
¤≕Pi
```

Fill those characters with the digits of `π`, including the leading `3.`, so `1997` decimals.

```python
Ｔ¹⁰⁰
```

Take only the `100` digits starting at the `997`th.

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 53 bytes

`BigMath.PI` guarantees accuracy for a number of digits up to its argument, but it outputs more digits than that (requiring truncation), and it just so happens that `BigMath.PI(99)` is still accurate enough for the problem, saving a byte over `BigMath.PI(101)`.

```ruby
require'bigdecimal/math'
p BigMath.PI(99).to_s[3,100]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hY-9DsFgFIZ3VyEWJNT5-77vnKGLzSCxi0hRNNGoagdX4CIsHbgod6MDs-l5lyd5n8ezrDe3pnnV1X6sb1emlzor0_4mO-zSbZYnp0meVMd-p-hOs8O8ndFiNjAbRtV5fV3yCAFWX_le1NW120NBZ-QdO7VgTKziyQuzMgVzQKqCFtAbm3FwCE4JLIiJtCJDUPQCntQTqFkLBRYlx0KIAXywXhz_u_Nr-gA)

Comment: People, don't upvote the CW, bringing it up on the vote list makes much cooler answers get less attention

Comment: I would note that mpmath is an external python library rather than in the standard libs

Answer (score 7):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 32 bytes

```
≔⊗Ｘχ¹⁰⁰θ≔θηＦφ≔⁺θ÷×η⁻φι⊕⊗⁻φιη✂Ｉη¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY2xCsMgFEX3fsUbn2BB50ylWTIUAu0PpOa1PjBK1KSfbxXSpePlHO4xdoomTK6US0r89tiH7eloxjF8KKJWErRSQkhYRXc6nFWCresVIlSjYjjA6LbU6OBzzzvPhA9eKKGVcGNfWbMlcPsbvIm0kM819ov@SaJ5rTRG9hnvjg3hdUoZbQVaiK6Uct7dFw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Calculates the first `1001` terms of `2 + 1/3*(2 + 2/5*(2 + 3/7*(2 + 4/9*(2 + ...))))`.

```
≔⊗Ｘχ¹⁰⁰θ
```

Calculate `2e100` as an integer.

```
≔θη
```

Start with that as an approximation to `1e100π`.

```
Ｆφ
```

Repeat `1000` times.

```
≔⁺θ÷×η⁻φι⊕⊗⁻φιη
```

Calculate the next approximation to `π`.

```
✂Ｉη¹
```

Output without the leading `3`.

Comment: I tried other formulae but they were usually longer and would also have needed to compute extra digits or have a correction value added. Also for comparison string compression results in a 45 byte program.

Answer (score 5):

### Python2, 91 bytes

```
print 0x296e417278c91bbebb472cab663a71405eef415a7751d7b251874642e34fa5406ba944ce62eb559eff7
```

Prints the first 100 digits starting at index 0.

Comment: Sadly, noting that `0x296e417278c91bbebb472cab663a71405eef415a7751d7b251874642e34fa5406ba944ce62eb559eff7 == 9*117127*3643891*0xbdbf77d0b437e74747cd86c65905fc322c302b55f1756ff0169afdbfcebffea23ca51e5` is not helpful, because if `c==a*b` then `c` never has more digits than `a*b`

Comment: I just checked 51197 digits of pi to see if any indexes other than 0 would be shorter, and they weren't.  Clever and well done, even if it won't win a prize.

Comment: @MarkRansom It could be possible to save bytes if there was a perfect square or power somewhere, ie writing `50digitnumber**2+smallremainder` instead of `100digitnumber`. But if the remainder also has 50 digits then it's useless.

Comment: Yes, I was just working on such a solution.

Comment: Also, I used hexadecimal, which effectively uses one byte to store 4 bits. I could try with a byte string which should effectively store 8 bits per byte.

Comment: The problem with a byte string is that any byte value over 127 requires 4 characters.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find a sequence that was even close to a perfect square.  The best was at index 8328 but it would require 94 characters after adding the remainder.

Comment: Can't I force python to read its sourcecode in latin-1 so that I can write all byte values between 0 and 255 using just one byte?

Comment: I suppose you could, but that would require an encoding comment.

Comment: I was thinking about what it would take to find a perfect square. Every 50-digit number can be squared to create a 100-digit number.  But that means your chances are 1 in 10^50. Even for a million tries your odds are still only 1 in 10^44.  Your odds of winning the Powerball jackpot 5 times in a row are higher.

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 24 bytes

Prints 100 digits of pi, starting at [index 2](https://api.pi.delivery/v1/pi?start=2&numberOfDigits=100)

```matlab
char(vpa(pi,102))(4:end)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc5BDoMgEEDRq7QrIHExzAwwUy/QaxC00YWWiPX61NVfveR/y5mvufey5MNeNdu6Dh7QOcuveZ9cXz@2nUfZqs17Gwz7oBgDBdGkhCQcMTKRECYNgCLsNfmopEopeAiCoImV@YYESXxkiCgRQVTvCBALBmL0PkFMKsa5cVpbteb9O468DI8tn2WZ29O48Z7qfw)

## MATLAB, <strike>30</strike> 28 bytes

```matlab
t=char(vpa(pi,102));t(4:end)
```

---

For both versions, this first uses variable precision calculation to work out Pi exactly to 102 *digits* (not decimals, it includes the `3`).

Then it converts the result to a character vector and removes the string prefix `'3.1'` to leave exactly 100 characters. For the Octave version we can index directly into the returned value from the `char()` function, while MATLAB we have to save to a variable then truncate.

```matlab
ans =
    4159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798
```

Notes:

- We have to use 102 instead of 101 (3 + 100 decimals), because the `vpa` function rounds the final digit. If we used 101 the final digit would be incorrect due to rounding.
- Based on [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7371/42295) meta post, when output is allowed to return a string, the `ans=` is acceptable.

Comment: @LuisMendo Ah yea, I'm used to wrapping in `@()` to avoid the `ans=` hence my mind was programmed to avoid the array access. In this case we are required to return a string (rather than STDOUT), which means the `ans=` appears to be [allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7371/42295).

Answer (score 3):

## [Kamilalisp](https://github.com/kspalaiologos/kamilalisp), 21 bytes

```
↓ 2\⍫← \○⊢*(fr 101)\π
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qOzE3MycxJ7O4YMFajcx8q_KizJLUnDwFjaWlJWm6FjcVHrVNVjCKedS7-lHbBIWYR9O7H3Ut0tJIK1IwNDDUjDnfAFG3SFMTwliwAEIDAA)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, <s>176</s> 171 bytes

```java
v->{var t=java.math.BigInteger.TEN.pow(100).shiftLeft(1);var p=t;for(int i=330;i>0;)p=t.add(p.multiply(t.valueOf(i)).divide(t.valueOf(i-~i--)));return(p+"").substring(1);}
```

Based on [my answer for the related challenge of outputting the first 500 digits of pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213932/52210).
-5 bytes thanks to *@Neil* by reverting the algorithm

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##TVA9a8MwEN3zK45MEsXCIaNwhkKGQusOLV1KB8WSnXNlWcgnlRDcv@7KbYYuB/eOe1@9Sqro9efSWDVN8KTQXTcA6MiEVjUG6nUFeKGAroOGvY2oIXGZ0XmTx0SKsIEaHFSwpOJwTSoAVX0mFoOis7jH7iHTdSaI12Mt/PjFdmXJxXTGlh5NS2zH5frkK5LtGFgWB6z2@1LioZQ8w0JpzbwYoiX09sJIJGWjeW4Zci40JtTmP1h8Y1FwzmUwFINj/m67zYLxNP3GWAXnRa72fTzZbP@WIq3hhtwB@8v7/gGK3wq4TGQGMUYSPp/IOuZEw1y0lt/amJcf)

Comment: Calculating in reverse increases accuracy allowing you to save bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVA9a8MwEN3zK45MEsXCIaNwhkKGQusOLV1KB8WSnXNlWcgnlRDcv@7KbYbecHDvuHsfvUqq6PXn0lg1TfCk0F03AOjIhFY1Bup1BHihgK6Dhr2NqCFxmdF5k9tEirCBGhxUsKTicE0qAFV9fiwGRWdxj91DfteZIF6PtfDjF9uVJRfTGVt6NC2xHZfrka9ItmNgmRyw2u9LiYdSZlQorZkXQ7SE3l4YiaRsNM8tQ86FxoTa/AeLbywKnksGQzE45u@220wYT9OvjZVwXuQq38eTzfJvLtJqbsgZsD@/7x@g@C2Ay0RmEGMk4fOKrGNONMxFa/ktjXn5AQ "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3, 165 bytes

(index 0)

```
s=''
a=10000
e=0
f=[a//5]*365
for c in range(364,0,-14):
 d=0
 for b in range(c,0,-1):
  d=d*b+f[b]*a;g=2*b-1;f[b]=d%g;d//=g
 s+=f"{e+d//a:04}";e=d%a
print(s[1:101])
```

[Try it in SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdj0FrhDAQhe%2DB%5FIdhl7JGd9W46kGZW6%2DFUgo9iIdkE0NoyYrxUkr%5Fe0d7KHQODx7vezDvCLMH451fYw6P%5Fh1e4c2H1S6gPtydsyPItgH9uVrKn5%2DgevHB5ZxxFvF04kyhLOk4s0gy4aCKohnTa9uQuy9wAx9gUcHZ5NrW5%5FJ8kbXoOAOz8bAh%2Dg%2D57cCeE2BSnU2DHlPVO6xSfZH9ZtE8uN4UBTrCYobT4ctm5FVX1t%2DH3lKuOJsXmpHEQXaylKPYPp59XBdAIE1mn4fkdzctqIX43wBE2AtDRb4axQ%2DraE%2DN&lang=sage) (with verification).

This algorithm only uses integer arithmetic. It was derived from obfuscated C code by Dik T. Winter, but I've modified it a bit over the years. Dik's version was a bit more compact, and can generate hundreds of digits, but it eventually produces erroneous output due to integer overflow, which isn't an issue in Python. OTOH, this algorithm gets a bit sluggish for large numbers of digits, due to the O(n^2) inner loop.

Of course, for serious pi digit generation, there are various lovely AGM based algorithms that converge quadratically. The Borwein brothers found several, but I like the Gauss / Brent / Salamin https://stackoverflow.com/a/26478803/4014959

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>45</s> 44 bytes

```
8₂;×•13CÒ₃Sˆ`£û‰ñêˆǝd‰Ž¿Ð†₆{©«62—lÚÌ”ß°dZγ•J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AV0Aov9vc2FiaWX//zjigoI7w5figKIxM0PDkuKCg1PLhmDCo8O74oCww7HDqsuGx51k4oCwxb3Cv8OQ4oCg4oKGe8Kpwqs2MuKAlGzDmsOM4oCdw5/CsGRazrPigKJK//8) Starts at index \$2{,}164{,}164{,}669{,}331\$.

Comment: This is nice, and (I think) the first answer to actually exploit 'compression' by choice of position.  It would be [40.5 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Nc3NCcJAEAbQViR4FTIzzs-WYQPCfusOCMGLydVGvOQiqcluPKgNvPfcbldg6vd1fS1zHuJ9OpMMMex3j06j9KMyaSKbQtFLIyNKV1hwKQm1Nkq9sKdTcDhACQMXDa6SUl3sC__8__MB) by porting to [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), but you deserve the credit for this & I won't post it separately...

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 70 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 8.75 bytes

```
u∆C₁⇧ḞḢḢṪ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwideKIhkPigoHih6fhuJ7huKLhuKLhuaoiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Calculates pi through \$cos^{-1}(-1)\$ and then formats to 100 decimal places.

### Explained

```
u∆C₁⇧ḞḢḢṪ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
u∆C        # ‎⁡arccos(-1)
   ₁⇧Ḟ     # ‎⁢Formatted to 102 decimal places
      ḢḢ   # ‎⁣Remove the `3.`
        Ṫ  # ‎⁤and the last digit. The last digit is needed for rounding purposes.
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 256 bytes

This version computes pi using an accelerated version of Archimedes' algorithm for `pi = 4*arctan(1)`.

```
m=338
M=1<<m
def s(y,x=M):
 y<<=m;u=x
 while u<0 or u>1:u=(x//2+y)//x-x;x+=u>>1
 return x
a=b=x=M
g=s(2*M)
d=[a]
for i in range(16):
 a=(a+g)>>1;p,d=d,[a];q=0
 for u in p:q+=2;d+=[d[-1]-(u>>q)]
 b-=b>>q;g=s(a*g>>m,g)
print(str(b*x//d[-1]*4*10**100>>m)[1:])
```

Try it in [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw1kM1q4zAUhfcGv8PFXYz8k8Zy2jLElmE6i64MpVBmkclCjmRHYEuOJM%5FYffreNFQgdOB%2D5xxxoyiCSUFnzQgPkAD3XBMah0EYAJ53Jx385nZwRv9wwE8nOUjLvRTwT1qnjAbT3dBnY09nboVHbjRCdQqhXy8N8KE3VvnzeOP%2DoPZSQ7vCawPFm9I9FHmxu6f5ff74XfysNLcrdGrBlMko7b8Lb%5FMXM3RSZFA8PmGSly4MoigKg7sPhu%5FfMBjZbvczDBpGqwqbhezAkTVbWBPvMWKtKjaWM1tQ%5Fz%2DrQcJc5WAszDXdz4ws222RrvF2u2yWcknZXNcUUSv9bDWgi7OWYVgY9MyRImlwZYId%2DDEMOkxRoDRYrntJ6NNXIWeEp32MMeWUCSYyZMsLy3F0NcxXw7S%5FpKwoRcoO4rChxw3B2kuMmdBuWIu6vLbxpK%5FrMeuxcrK4GeK8JW2CX%5F5yJQ8JzRO8OVLxge6PCN7hVsobPUhNPuL4E7%2DVi4A=&lang=python)

This code implements binary fixed point arithmetic using Python integers. The core arctan algorithm was devised by Bille Carlson, see Carlson, B. C. [An Algorithm for Computing Logarithms and Arctangents](https://doi.org/10.2307/2005182), Mathematics of Computation, Apr 1972.

This algorithm rapidly calculates any of the standard inverse circular and hyperbolic functions. It even handles complex arguments (assuming the sqrt function does). Here's a [non-golfed demo](https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/a4655b6029d78d449a8aa28c3986bf89) that computes `pi = 10*arcsin((sqrt(5)-1)/4)`.

This algorithm is very similar to the AGM (arithmetic-geometric mean), but it updates the two core terms `a` and `g` sequentially instead of in parallel. So it's sometimes referred to as the fake AGM. It's also known as Borchardt's modified AGM algorithm. The Borwein brothers pointed out that it is, in fact, the same algorithm Archimedes used to iteratively subdivide a polygon.

Carlson's innovation is to apply Richardson series acceleration, which speeds up the convergence considerably. It's not as fast as a true AGM, however it's quite efficient for high precision calculation because it only uses one non-trivial division. (The square root can be also be implemented to avoid non-trivial divisions, using the [Quake-style 1/sqrt algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70841843/4014959)).

For further details on algorithms related to pi and the AGM, please see [The Borwein brothers, Pi and the AGM](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.07558) by Richard P. Brent.

FWIW, Carlson also developed and analysed a suite of true AGM algorithms for computing elliptic integrals and functions, and those algorithms can (of course) handle circular & hyperbolic functions. See [Numerical computation of real or complex elliptic integrals](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9409227)