# Print 100 digits of Champernowne's Constant

Tags: code-golf, math, number

<sub>Inspired by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66878/find-the-number-in-the-champernowne-constant) and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265634/print-100-digits-of-%cf%80) question</sub>

##### Challenge

Your challenge is to print any 100 consecutive digits of Champernowne's Constant. You must give the index at which that subsequence appears. The 0 at the beginning is not included.

For example, you could print any of the following:

```
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Index|Output                                                                                              |
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0    |1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545|
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|50   |0313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798|
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|100  |5565758596061662636465666768697071727374757677787980818283848586878889909192939495969798991001011021|
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

##### Rules

- Output may be  a string/digit list/etc.
- You may provide a function or a program
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins!

Comment: Since Champerone's constant is normal, you can output any 100 digits, as long as you know the index where they appear.

Comment: @Neil Ah okay that makes sense, I couldn't remember if it was normal or not, so I think I just guessed.

Comment: This is a [chameleon challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8214/20260) for "print any 100 digits".

Comment: @Neil and the calculation of that index is trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `H`, 14 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 1.75 bytes

```
1ẋ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJIPSIsIiIsIjHhuosiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Bitstring:

```
01000010111110
```

Prints `1` 100 times, same as APL

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>4 3</s>  2 bytes

```
³Ṭ
```

A full program that accepts no arguments and prints a list of one hundred consecutive places starting at the 0-indexed index (you may need to scroll):

$$98888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888890$$

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q5oc71/z/DwA)**

#### How?

By definition, Champernowne's constant's decimal places are the concatenation of the natural numbers, so \$10^{99}\$, the first number with \$100\$ decimal digits, appears.

The index of \$N = 10^{99}\$ may be calculated like so:

$$d = \text{digit_length}(N) = \lfloor log_{10}(N) \rfloor + 1$$
$$\text{index} = d \times N - \frac{10^{d}-1}{9}$$
$$= 100 \times 10^{99}-\frac{10^{100}-1}{9}$$
$$= 10^{101}-\frac{10^{100}-1}{9}$$
$$=98888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888889$$

The next digit of Champernowne's constant after the last zero of \$N\$ is the first digit of \$N+1\$ which is \$1\$, so let's get the trailing \$99\$ zeros of \$N\$ and a \$1\$...

```
³Ṭ - Main Link: no arguments
³  - 100
 Ṭ - untruth -> [0,0,0,...,1] (99 zeros followed by a one)
   - implicit print
```

---

##### Original @ 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page):

```
55ḊV
```

A full program that accepts no arguments and prints the 2<sup>nd</sup> to 101<sup>st</sup> decimal places.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/U9OGOrrD//wE)**

#### How?

```
55ḊV - Main Link: no arguments
55   - fifty-five
  Ḋ  - dequeue -> [2,3,4,...,54,55]
   V - evaluate as Jelly code -> (integer) 234...5455
     - implicit print
```

Comment: Oh, dammit, that's clever lol. Also I'll have to keep using `V` to flatten digits into a number in mind, that's a cool trick.

Answer (score 7):

## C, 41 bytes

```
main(i){for(i=9;i++<59;)printf("%d",i);}
```

Goes through numbers 10 to 59 (indexes 9 to 108), printing exactly 100 digits (without a newline).

---

## C, 28 bytes

```
main(){printf("1%099d",0);}
```

Inspired by Jonathan Allan's solution, just prints 10^99, starting at index 98888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888889 (if my short Python script did not fail me :p):

```
n = 0

for i in range(1, 100):
  n = n + 9 * pow(10, i - 1) * i

print(n)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 23 bytes

```
-[----->+>+<<]>-[->..<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN1oXBOy07bRtbGLtgFw7PT2b2P//AQ)

Outputs 100 `3`s, which appears at index 16888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888872.

This program first obtains the value 51 (which is the ASCII code of `3`), calculating it as 255/5, in two cells. It then decrements one of those cells to 50, and then uses it as a counter for a loop in which each iteration outputs the other cell's value twice.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
2r55DF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9@oyNTUxe3/fwA)

Starts at index 1 (digit 2 in the number `2`). Range from 2 to 55 and then the decimal representation of each, then flattened.

Comment: Haha - I didn't golf this and make a post in 9 seconds.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I knew there was something I was missing in place of `DF` lmao. Also yeah not sure why I didn't think of using dequeue directly on `55`; I thought I'd have to do `55RḊ`; my rustiness is showing xD

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
100⍴1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#%23SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/g8EhgYGj3q3GAIA)

Prints 1, one hundred times. Similar approach to @Jonathan Allan and others.
First appears as

```apl
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 #fifty-one 1s
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111(12)
```

Index is \$51\cdot\frac{10^{51}-1}{9}+ \sum_{n=1}^{50}(9n \cdot 10^{n}) = \frac{5}{9}(10^{53}-1)-4\$.
Explicitly, this is \$55555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555551\$ (fifty-one 5s and one 1).

## 7 bytes

If we want to print as a string rather than a list.

```apl
100⍴'1'
```

[Here's a more legit APL solution by Graham](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267386/117598)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

```
⭆⁵⁰⁺χι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaJga6CgE5JQWaxgCGZmamprW////1y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Starts at index `9`. Explanation: Loops over the first `50` integers adding `10` to each, then joins everything together.

Alternative version, also 6 bytes:

```
⪫…χ⁶⁰ω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMrPzNPIygxLz1Vw9BAR8HMQFNHoVxT0/r///@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code. Starts at index `9`. Explanation: Lists the integers from `10` to `60`, then joins everything together.

Alternatively, starting at index `1`, also for 6 bytes:

```
⭆⁵⁴⁺²ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaJia6CgE5JQWaxjpKGRqampa////X7csBwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Loops over the first `54` integers adding `2` to each, then joins everything together.

Boring 4-byte solution:

```
”)；e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREPJgA5ASdP6////umU5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Starts at index `988888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888890`. Explanation: Compressed string of `100` `0`s.

Slightly less boring 5-byte solution:

```
ＩＸφ³³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEIyC/PLVIw9DAwEBHwdhYU1PT@v///7plOQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Starts at index `98888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888889`. Explanation: Calculates `1000³³`.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>5</s> 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
1т×
```

-2 bytes porting [*@Tbw*'s APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267388/52210).

Outputs at 0-based index \$55555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555551\$.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8GLT4en//wMA)

**Original 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answer(s):**

- `Y55ŸJ` - Outputs at 0-based index \$1\$ - [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/0tT06A6v//8B);
- `T59ŸJ` - Outputs at 0-based index \$9\$ - [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/xNTy6A6v//8B);
- `46₃ŸJ` - Outputs at 0-based index \$81\$ - [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fxOxRU/PRHV7//wMA).

Here also the program with an infinite list of all valid outputs:

```
∞Sü100J
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce84MN7DA0MvP7/BwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
1т      # Push 1; Push 100
  ×     # Pop both, and push a string of 100 1s
        # (which is output implicitly as result)

Y55     # Push 2; Push 55
   Ÿ    # Pop both, and push a list in the range [2,55]
    J   # Join the list together to a single string
        # (which is output implicitly as result)

T59     # Push 10; Push 59
   ŸJ   # Same as above

46₃     # Push 46; Push 95
   ŸJ   # Same as above
```

```python
∞       # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 S      # Convert it to a flattened list of digits
  ü100  # Pop and push a list of all overlapping lists of 100 digits
      J # Join each inner list of digits together to a string
        # (after which this infinite list is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

i byte saved thank to Tbw

A function taking no arguments with output from index 2 with index origin = 1

```
1↓⊃,/⍕¨⍳55
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv@GjtsmPupp19B/1Tj204lHvZlPT/0AJrv9pXAA)

Comment: You can save a byte by dropping the high minus `¯`. Then you get one index over by starting at 2.

Comment: @Tbw Thanks. Code edited.

Answer (score 2):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 17 bytes

```
/10/00000001/1100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X9/QQN8AAgz1DQ0NDP7/BwA)

Outputs 98 `0`s followed by 2 `1`s, which appears (in `1[000...0001 1]000...0002`) at index 98888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888990.

The replacement multiplies the number of `0`s by 7 as they move across each `1`.

---

Some alternative solutions, of the same length:

```
/10/0001/10010110
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X9/QQN/AwMAQSBsYGhgaGvz/DwA)

Outputs 96 `0`s followed by 4 `1`s.

```
/10/00001/0110010
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X9/QQN8ACAz1DQwNgZTB//8A)

Outputs 97 `0`s followed by 3 `1`s.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 6 bytes

```
55,(;5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/39RUR8Pa9P9/AA)

Prints the first 100 digits.

```
55,    # the list 0..55
   (;  # drop the 0
     5 # push 5 to the stack
# the stack is implicitly printed without separator
```

Alternatively, this one prints a hundred 1s:

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 6 bytes

```
1+100*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/31Db0MBA6/9/AA)

Gets `"1"` by appending 1 to the implicit empty input, then repeats it 100 times.