# Generate this huge right triangle

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

Your task is to print out this exact text:

```
-
||
-|-
|---
|-|--
-|-|--
-|-----
|-|-----
|---|-|--
-|-----|--
---|-|-----
|---|-|-----
|---|-----|--
-----|---|-|--
-|-|---|-------
------|---|-----
|-|---------|-|--
---|-----|---|----
-|-----|-|---------
|-|---|-|-----------
|-----------|---|-|--
-|-----|-|---------|--
---|-----|-----|-|-----
|---|-|---------|-------
------|---|-|---|--------
-----|-----|---------|-|--
-|-----|-------|-----|-----
|---|-----|-------|---|-----
--|---------|-|---------|-|--
---|---|-----|-------|---|-|--
-|-----------|-------|---|-----
--|---|-----|-----------|-|-----
------------|-----|---------|----
-|-----|-|-----|---------|-----|--
---|-|-----|-----|---|-|-----------
|---------|-|---|-----|-----|-|-----
------|---|-----|-------|---------|--
-----|---------|-------|-----|-----|--
-|-------|-----|---|-------|---|-------
------|---------|-----------|-|---------
```

It at first look seems meaningless repititions of `-` and `|`, but it has a nice hidden pattern inside it. I won't reveal it now.

Binary matrix or 2D lists are not accepted as output. Exactly this text is required. But output can have trailing whitespace.

You can use any non-number character in place of `-` and `|`

Shortest code wins.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861) This looks like a reasonably well-specified challenge, but for future reference, we strongly recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to the main site. For example, [posting challenges with "hidden" patterns is strongly discouraged](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19231).

Comment: (for those who haven't figured it out, the `|`s are at the prime positions, 1-indexed)

Comment: Is a leading newline ok?

Comment: can we take the number of lines as input?

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 70 bytes

```python
p=n=i=1
while i<41:s='';exec"s+='-|'[p%n];p*=n*n;n+=1;"*i;i+=1;print s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8A2zzbT1pCrPCMzJ1Uh08bE0KrYVl3dOrUiNVmpWNtWXbdGPbpANS/WukDLNk8rzzpP29bQWkkr0zoTxCgoyswrUSj@/x8A)

> *The `|`s mark the position of primes.*
>  The idea here, as with many prime-related tasks in Python, is to use [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem). Essentially, \$ (n - 1)!^2 \bmod n \$ will equal 1 if \$ n \$ is prime, and 0 if it is not. [@xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) gives a more in-depth explanation [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27022/88546) if you're interested.

Comment: [Alwin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/105030/alwin) left a [message in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58593213#58593213) with a bit of a spoiler as to how this works, as well as a request for a more in-depth explanation of the specific mathematical trick used here (I'm being deliberately vague, their chat message should make it clearer)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I've given a short explanation as to how this works, as requested.

Answer (score 10):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>29 26</sup> 25 bytes

```
({&'-|'/.1 p:#\)@(#~i.41)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NarV1HVr1PX1DBUKrJRjNB00lOsy9UwMNf9rcqUmZ@QrpCmoq/8HAA)

<sup>-3 thanks to an idea from Lynn!</sup>

<sup>-1 thanks to xash!</sup>

Comment: Maybe something like `(]/.'-|'{~1 p:#\)#~i.41`  works (I don't understand the rules for posting J here well enough to know if that counts as a full answer or not, but the main idea is to use #\ ).

Comment: Thanks Lynn!  The rules are just that the submission must be assignable to a function like `f=:<your submission>`.  In this case it meant we just had to surround in parenthesis and use the `@` since the `verb@noun` creates another legal verb.

Comment: -1 with inlining to `({&'-|'/.…`. Nice way to create the triangle.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 11 bytes

```
40RRȷR¤ṁẒỌY
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCI0MFJSyLdSwqThuYHhupLhu4xZIiwiIiwiIixbXV0=)

> The `|`s are at prime indexes

I figured out the pattern by smash-printing the rows into one flat string and realizing that the distribution looked familiar :P I had another idea to use base conversion but I decided to flatten the string first and then noticed.

Leaky Nun has two tricks in [their answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231195/68942) - firstly, that you can take the range up to `1000` (which is shorter) since `mold` will discard extras, and secondly, I didn't notice other characters were allowed, so the digraph nilad `ØA` is shorter. Jonathan Allan also noticed that we can just use `chr` and output the unprintables 0x00 and 0x01, so thanks to both of them for the byte saves. Please go upvote Leaky Nun's answer as well.

```
40RRȷR¤ṁẒỌY  Main Link (Niladic)
40           Start at 40
  R          Range; [1, 2, ..., 40]
   R         Range; [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], ...]
       ṁ     Mold; to the shape of [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], ...], reshape
    ȷR¤      Range of 1000 ([1, 2, 3, ..., 1000]) - extra elements are discarded
        Ẓ    x => isprime(x)
         Ọ   chr
          Y  Join on newlines
```

There are a couple of ways to go about this idea - you can swap which list you generate first, you can index into a multitude of other strings, you can prime-check before or after molding since it vectorizes and thus doesn't really care what shape it is, etc.

Comment: No need to index into anything, `Ọ` will do fine by the given rules.

Comment: @JonathanAllan ah, good find

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
ȷRẒṁ40RR¤ịØAY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//yLdS4bqS4bmBNDBSUsKk4buLw5hBWf//)

Uses `Z` and `A` instead of `-` and `|`.

This is basically the same answer as [@hyper-neutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyper-neutrino)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231193/48934), which was published 3 minutes before mine, but our answers arose independently.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with `ȷRẒṁ40RR¤ỌY` which saves two.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
A820ÅTüŸ€¦pèJ»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9vc2FiaWX//0E4MjDDhVTDvMW44oKswqZww6hKwrv//w)

-1 byte thanks to ovs

```
A820ÅT>üŸ€¦pèJ»  Full Program
A                Push "abc...xyz"
 820             Push 820
    ÅT           Pop 820; Push [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, ...] (triangular numbers)
      üŸ         Pairwise range; get [[0, 1], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6], ...]
        €¦       For each sublist, remove the first element
          p      Primality; get the 2D list of 1s and 0s
           è     Index into "abc...xyz"
            J    Join each row into a string
              »  Join the result into a multiline string
```

Comment: `>üŸ€¨` -> `üŸ€¦` for -1

Comment: And there a few other ways to get the list of triangular numbers, such as `41L2c` and `820ÅT`, but I couldn't find anything shorter.

Comment: @ovs Oh, oops, I was on the wrong branch's info.txt so I didn't see the triangular numbers built-in. Thanks! Although, isn't `820ÅT` the same length as `40ÝÝO`, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah it is the same length, I should've been a bit clearer in my previous comment ;). Just wanted to point out that builtin exists.

Comment: @ovs Ah, I see, I believe I misread your comment :) thanks though.

Comment: I've posted [my 9-byter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233634/52210) as a separated answer, since the approach is fairly different. It would have been [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8VHHPBMDn0OLCw6v8Dq0@/9/AA) if I'd use characters `ab` as well. (PS: There is a small error in your explanation: the `Pop 40; ...` should be `Pop 820; ...`. Probably a left-over from your initial `40ÝÝO`?)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ØYxJĠẒỌY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjMgKryMLHu6a9HB3T@T//wA)

```
ØY         The string "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"
  xJ       Repeat "B" once, "C" twice, "D" thrice... "z" 40 times.
    Ġ      Group indices by values: [[1], [2,3], [4,5,6], …, […820]]
                                     ↑B   ↑C     ↑D          ↑z
     Ẓ     Is prime?
      Ọ    Translate 0,1 into "\x00","\x01"
       Y   Join lines
```

Answer (score 5):

## Excel, 110 bytes

```
=LET(a,SEQUENCE(820),CONCAT(IF(MMULT((MOD(a,TRANSPOSE(a))=0)*1,a^0)=2,"|","-")&IF(MOD(SQRT(8*a+1),1),"","
")))
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnEVkHnsSzG5dz3kf?e=jllJVx)

```
=LET(a,SEQUENCE(820),                               a = (1..820)
CONCAT(                                             concatenate the following
IF(MMULT((MOD(a,TRANSPOSE(a))=0)*1,a^0)=2,"|","-")& if a is prime (has 2 factors) then "|" else "-"
IF(MOD(SQRT(8*a+1),1),"","                          if a is triangular (8a+1 is a perfect square) then add a line feed
")))
```

Comment: You can use `ROW(1:820)` instead of `SEQUENCE(820)` to save 3 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 16 bytes

```
40ɾƛʁƛkA¥›:£æi;ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=40%C9%BE%C6%9B%CA%81%C6%9BkA%C2%A5%E2%80%BA%3A%C2%A3%C3%A6i%3B%E1%B9%85&inputs=&header=&footer=)

-1 byte thanks to @hyper-neutrino

> Replace all those characters with numbers from 1, 2 and so on. The |'s are at prime indices. So then it's easy.

> (pxeger spoiled it, though I came to it independently)

Comment: Actually, following a tip from Jonathan Allan, you can use `\x00` and `\x01` so you can just use `chr` instead of indexing: [Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=40%C9%BE%C6%9B%CA%81%C6%9B%C2%A5%E2%80%BA%3A%C2%A3%C3%A6C%3B%E1%B9%85&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: [13 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=k1%C9%BE40%C9%BE%C9%BE%E2%80%A2%C3%A6Cv%E2%88%91%E2%81%8B&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 19 bytes

```
jmsm@GP_hkrZ=+ZdS40
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pyu3ONfBPSA@I7soylY7KiXYxOD/fwA)

Uses `a` and `b` instead of `-` and `|`.

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 1249 bytes

```
++++++++++[>+>++++>++++++<<<-]>>.<.>>..<<.>.>.<.<.>>.<...<.>>.<.>.<..<.>.>.<.>.<..<.>.>.<.....<.>>.<.>.<.....<.>>.<...>.<.>.<..<.>.>.<.....>.<..<.>...>.<.>.<.....<.>>.<...>.<.>.<.....<.>>.<...>.<.....>.<..<.>.....>.<...>.<.>.<..<.>.>.<.>.<...>.<.......<.>......>.<...>.<.....<.>>.<.>.<.........>.<.>.<..<.>...>.<.....>.<...>.<....<.>.>.<.....>.<.>.<.........<.>>.<.>.<...>.<.>.<...........<.>>.<...........>.<...>.<.>.<..<.>.>.<.....>.<.>.<.........>.<..<.>...>.<.....>.<.....>.<.>.<.....<.>>.<...>.<.>.<.........>.<.......<.>......>.<...>.<.>.<...>.<........<.>.....>.<.....>.<.........>.<.>.<..<.>.>.<.....>.<.......>.<.....>.<.....<.>>.<...>.<.....>.<.......>.<...>.<.....<.>..>.<.........>.<.>.<.........>.<.>.<..<.>...>.<...>.<.....>.<.......>.<...>.<.>.<..<.>.>.<...........>.<.......>.<...>.<.....<.>..>.<...>.<.....>.<...........>.<.>.<.....<.>............>.<.....>.<.........>.<....<.>.>.<.....>.<.>.<.....>.<.........>.<.....>.<..<.>...>.<.>.<.....>.<.....>.<...>.<.>.<...........<.>>.<.........>.<.>.<...>.<.....>.<.....>.<.>.<.....<.>......>.<...>.<.....>.<.......>.<.........>.<..<.>.....>.<.........>.<.......>.<.....>.<.....>.<..<.>.>.<.......>.<.....>.<...>.<.......>.<...>.<.......<.>......>.<.........>.<...........>.<.>.<.........
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVNbCsIwEDxQcU6w5CLihwqCCH4Inj82lbTp7GzSfDSdfWUzs7l9rs/343t/5Tyt65ymVPb0h2Z2uqQEw/yBzRsKWKAB9WcB1bkDoKANQgevhsYvk9hIydWo21sztnByUNPgUnRoRXyVNn9Xkp3NbdrzOixxa7KtAyxiRAczRgwjJskHsEVLqPUIDuqp06vqusTRBtS9HdEQNQXlkapKneBt@EHsDpaXNBgVxYJXMnh3GAgv2JcPSmBqDQMtysr5Bw)

Kind of boring; just a hardcoded solution. I'm trying to create a solution that computes it with the prime relation, but I'm not that experienced in brainfuck and also I'll need to find an interpreter that goes up to 820 if I don't want excessive pain and suffering.

Comment: [-11 bytes](https://tio.run/##jVPRCsMgEPugw3yB@CNlD9tgMAZ7GOz7nd2wdbmorVDMeXfGRC@v8/15e18fOYdlCSGdopnFUIalAhCRAta/IcB@0IA6@YIyhwOgpB1CJ2@BZl0WcZCKa1DT2yr2dFog0uBWtGlFfJS2/q8lLzanafcbqMTUJK0DKmImBytGCqMvkk/giLZQ@9HZaOTOqKtjiaME1Lmd0BA9heQ9V5U7nbfhL@LwYnlLO1dFqeCd7Lw7TIwX6ssHJTBRw8SL9cv5Aw) with a slightly shorter initializer.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>23</s> 19 bytes

‒1 thanks to Razetime.

Full program.

```apl
↑⎕UCS{1⍭⍳≢⍵}⍢∊,\⍳40
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94P@jtomP@qaGOgdXGz7qXfuod/OjzkWPerfWPupd9KijSycGKGJiAFL6vwAA)

`⍳40` **i**ndices 1 through 40

`,\` prefixes of that; `[1,[1,2],[1,2,3],`…`,39,40]]`

`{`…`}⍢∊` apply the following anonymous lambda to the **e**nlisted (flattened) data:

`⍵` the argument; `[1,1,2,1,2,3,`…`,39,40]`

`≢` the length of that; `820`

> `1⍭` indicate which elements are prime; `[0,1,1,0,1,0,`…`,0,0]`

`⎕UCS` convert to characters in the **U**niversal **C**haracter **S**et; `[\x00,\x01,\x01,\x00,\x01,\x00,`…`,\x00,\x00]`

`↑` mix the list of strings into a matrix, padding with spaces as necessary to make it rectangular; `["\x00`    …`","\x01\x01`    …`",`…`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`…`\x00\x00"]`

Comment: may want to use `⎕A` instead of `'-|'`

Comment: @Razetime Ah, right.

Comment: @Shaggy Oh, right. I read that as not being able to return numbers. My bad; should be fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 223 bytes

```
-[>-<-----]>[>++++[<[[->>>+<<<]>]<+>>>-]<-]>>-[--->+<]>[<<<<<[>+[[>]>]>>[->+>]>[[-<+>]<<[-<<<[[<]<]>>[-]-[[>]>]>]+>>>>]<<<<<<<[[<]<]<]>+[->>>]<[-<+>]<-]<<<+<+<--[>[[[-<<<+>>>]>]<<-[---<+>]<.[-]<+<-]++++++++++.[-]>[-<+>]+<<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9BCkIxEEMPNIwnCLlIyEIFQQQXguevmf6P6aKleUmnt8/1@X5876@1Wmz0yBQrEqQmWQBMo3JuIz5b4WIExSgBiYHIRCp7ogk4Vo8vGNt0n6CnboCjYANBaj9pnPEeoLI680m7bIIzD/YUG7ukeCDXX3PFoyUf8Fo/)

Uses trial division up to 86 to determine every prime up to 820.  Outputs `T` for `-` and `V` for `|`.

```
Populate list of 820 numbers not yet considered composite
-[>-<-----]>[>++++[<[[->>>+<<<]>]<+>>>-]<-]

tape is 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 etc 1 0 0 1 0 (0)

Create 85 to test visibility by up to N=86 (which is high enough and short to create)
>>-[--->+<]>

working tape will be 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 etc 1 1 0 1 1 0 (0 or 1) x y 0 0
with x plus y = 85 in first iteration

For all numbers from 85 down to 1: (N is this number plus one)
[

  For all numbers to sieve:
  <<<<<[

    Mark number seen
    >+

    Decrement x and increment y if x is nonzero
    [[>]>]>>[->+>]

    Otherwise, the last number was divisible by N
    >[

      Move y back to x
      [-<+>]

      If this isn't the first time we've seen a multiple of N:
      <<[

        Mark number composite
        -<<<[[<]<]>>[-]-[[>]>]>

      Mark that we've seen a multiple of N
      ]+>>>>

    ]

    Go to next number (for loop termination condition)
    <<<<<<<[[<]<]<

  Repeat until all 820 numbers checked
  ]

  Remove all "seen" markings and "seen multiple of N"
  >+[->>>]

  Copy whatever was left of y back to x and decrement
  <[-<+>]<-
]

Now all numbers have been checked and marked composite if applicable
We are 5 cells right of first number (1) now

Set up counters for triangle shape (x=1 for first row; and y=1 so y is always nonzero)
<<<+<+

Mark 1 as nonprime
<--

For each number
[

  While x is nonzero
  >[

    Move x and y left three cells
    [[-<<<+>>>]>]

    Add 85 to primality indicator to output ASCII
    <<-[---<+>]

    Output and remove number
    <.[-]

    Increment y and decrement x
    <+<-

  ]

  Output newline
  ++++++++++.[-]

  Copy y to x (now one more than it was; restore y=1)
  >[-<+>]+

<<]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 98 bytes

```python
r=range
for _ in r(n:=1,41):s="";exec("s+='-|'[all(n%y for y in r(2,n))and n>1];n+=1;"*_);print(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v8i2KDEvPZUrLb9IIV4hM0@hSCPPytZQx8RQ06rYVknJOrUiNVlDqVjbVl23Rj06MSdHI0@1UgGkvBKi3EgnT1MzMS9FIc/OMNY6T9vW0FpJK17TuqAoM69Eo1jz/38A)

-6 bytes thanks to @hyper-neutrino and @pxeger

Comment: why 46? (padding)

Comment: [101 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8/WkCstv0ghXiEzT6EoMS89VcNQx8RQ0yq1IjVZQ6mgKDOvRCM1L8VWXbdGPToxJ0cjT7VSAaSjEqHDSCdPUzMxL0Uhz84wVtM6T9vW0FpJK17TGqJd8/9/AA), and the 46 should be a 41 (consistent tip - if you want to output a single string without a trailing newline, `end=x` is shorter than `x,end=""`)

Comment: [98 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3k9LyixTiFTLzFIoS89JTNfKsbA11TAw1rYptlZSsUytSkzWUirVt1XVr1KMTc3I08lQrFUBaKhFajHTyNDUT81IU8uwMY63ztG0NrZW04jWtC4oy80o0ijUhNkEthFkMAA)

Comment: @hyper-neutrino sorry was a mistake

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 105 bytes

```python
r=range
for i in r(1,41):
	for j in r(i):n=i*~-i//2-~j;print(end="-|"[all(n%y for y in r(2,n))])
	print()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8i2KDEvPZUrLb9IIVMhM0@hSMNQx8RQ04qLEySUBRHK1LTKs83UqtPN1Nc30q3Lsi4oyswr0UjNS7FV0q1Rik7MydHIU61UAGmphGgx0snT1IzV5OKEKNX8/x8A)

One byte longer than wasif's, but no `exec` trick used here.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by doing some extra unnecessary work: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JctLCoAgEADQdZ5CgsCJRPqsBE8SLYKsJmKKoY0QXt0Itw/eHZ79oj4ldjzT5sV6sUSJJFm1zdCCFcVPRyYEezPSozwtrtRvOc7nqRTWUaMxnY4HVEH@IeTQNQgwgShyg5Q@) (:

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>13</s> 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Uses `f` for composites and `t` for primes.

```
#(õ_ç Ëî°Tj
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=Iyj1X%2bcgy%2b6wVGo)

```
#(õ_ç Ëî°Tj
#(              :40
  õ             :Range [1,40]
   _            :Map each Z
    ç           :  Z spaces (could be any character)
      Ë         :  Map each character
       î        :    Slice the following to length (always 1)
        °T      :      Prefix increment T (initially 0)
          j     :      Is prime? (Returns a Boolean which gets coerced to a string by î)
                :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Preserving this version as I quite liked the `ú` trick. Uses `q` for qomposites(!) and `p` for primes.

```
40õ_ç¬Ëú²g°Tj
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=NDD1X%2besy/qyZ7BUag)

```
40õ_ç¬Ëú²g°Tj
40õ_              :Map each Z in the range [1,40]
    ç             :  Repeat to that length
     ¬            :    "q"
      Ë           :  Map each character
       ú          :    Left pad
        ²         :    With "p" to length 2
         g        :    Get the character at index
          °Tj     :      As above, with the Boolean this time coerced to 0 or 1
                  :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES7), 78 bytes

A recursive function going from \$k=820\$ to \$k=1\$ and testing whether \$\sqrt{8k+1}\$ is an integer to detect triangular numbers and figure out where line-feeds have to be inserted.

```javascript
f=(k=820)=>k?f(k-1)+'-|'[(g=n=>n%--d?g(n):+!~-d)(d=k)]+[`
`[(1+8*k)**.5%1]]:''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoMwEADAe3/Rg2Q3YaUpFERYfUgIKMaENrIptfQkfj2dec2/eV8@z/eXpIS11siQubvfkIc8Rshk0Sg6lIPEwoM0RGFMINib60kBIXBGb9x0mRxY0@mMWrePxnrfK1WXInvZ1nYrCSIg1j8)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>101</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>98</s></sup> 97 bytes

```c
p;r;d;f(n){for(n=r=0;++r<41;puts(""))for(;r*-~r>2*n;printf(L"-|"+p))for(p=d=n++;d>1;p=n%d--&&p);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBCsIwEADveUUJWHYbFlS8rekL/ERJSCnoGrYVD7U@3RhxrjMTaAyhlMzKkRMIrumuIF79np3T8@nA@bHMYC3iz7B29Nb@2AlnnWRJcLH0si7/dfbRi3Mc@/p52UWits3IW6ltcxsmATSraSoJkM1WPiFdh3Eu9PwC)

Saved a byte (and got below \$100\$!) thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!
Saved another byte thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)!!!
Saved yet another byte from [Juan Ignacio Díaz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/112488/juan-ignacio-d%c3%adaz)!!!

Comment: [98 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYtBCsIwEADvfUUNWHYbFlS8rekL/ERJSCnoGrYtHmp9ujHiXGfG0@B9zomVA0cQXONDQZy6A1url/OR0zJPYAziz7C29Nbu1AonHWWOcDUvMnaX/j654MRaDl0ZnewDUdMk5C2XuL73owBWa1UXIiBXW/74eOuHKdPzCw)

Comment: @Shaggy Nioce one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, <s>11</s> 14 bytes

```
40ƛɽ÷Ṡnɾ+æ₁+Cṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=40%C6%9B%C9%BD%C3%B7%E1%B9%A0n%C9%BE%2B%C3%A6%E2%82%81%2BC%E1%B9%85&inputs=&header=&footer=)

<s>I'm posting this because it's significantly shorter than the other one.</s> I didn't realise the *non-number* rule, but still fairly short.

```
40ƛ            # Map 1...40 to...
   ɽ÷Ṡ         # Sum of 1...n-1 
      nɾ+      # Added to each of 1...n, this produces the correct indices
         æ     # Is prime (vectorised)
          ₁+C  # Add 100 and get the corresponding character (d or e)
             ṅ # Joined
               # (j flag) join by newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞40L£pçJ»
```

Uses unprintables `\0` and `\1` instead of `-` and `|`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8EwOfQ4sLDi/3OrT7/38A)

**Explanation:**

```python
∞         # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 40L      # Push list [1,2,3,...,38,39,40]
    £     # Split the first list into parts with the lengths of the second list
          # (removes any unused trailing items): [[1],[2,3],[4,5,6],...]
     p    # Check for each integer whether it's a prime (1 if it's a prime; 0 otherwise)
      ç   # Convert it to a character with this codepoint: \0 and \1
       J  # Join each inner list together to a single string
        » # And join those strings by newlines
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 75 bytes

```
820 [1,b] [ prime? 43 45 ? ] ""map-as 40 [1,b] [ cut swap print ] each drop
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcu7DsIwEETRXxmlBsTDSAiKlBENDaKKUixmIVHiB2tH@XzHQEF3NTrzJB2dpNv1fKmOMBTblZfOcPi1kH3l7lksDwj8HtnqPHQOp3TYrlFvFvcGNb6nEmoHtUeJBkVhyC8pQP2RHiPCRP6jbcyISbd4iPMpzQ)

- `820 [1,b]` Create a range from 1 to 820 inclusive. 820 is the number of elements in the triangle sans newlines.
- `[ prime? 43 45 ? ] ""map-as` Create a flat version of the triangle as a string, where `43` is the code point for `+` and `45` is the code point for `-`. `|`'s code point has 3 digits so I changed this (as it is allowed by the rules).
- `40 [1,b] [ cut swap print ] each drop` Cut the sequence in two at ever-increasing indices, printing each line after it is cut off from the main sequence.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 60 bytes

```
820$*|
.(?<=^\1+(..+))
-
^.
-¶
+`(.)+¶(?=.+$)(?<-1>.)+.
$&¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy8LIQEWrhktPw97GNi7GUFtDT09bU5NLlytOj0v30DYu7QQNPU3tQ9s07G31tFU0gcp0De2AInpcKmqHtv3/DwA) Explanation:

```
820$*|
```

Insert 820 `|`s. (820 = 40 × 41 ÷ 2)

```
.(?<=^\1+(..+))
-
```

Change most of them to `-`s appropriately.

```
^.
-¶
```

Change the first one too, and start building the triangle.

```
+`(.)+¶(?=.+$)(?<-1>.)+.
$&¶
```

Build up each row of the triangle to be one character longer than the previous.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
Ｇ↓→⁴⁰ψ¤⭆⁸²⁰§-|﹪ΠＥ⊕ι∨λ±¹⊕ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYrLCsIwEADvfsXS0wa2oOJB2pMgQg/Vol8Q0pAG1qyE@Cj47zE9OpeBYcykoxHNOQ/Cs5OAzVHegaC5ejclgt2aYFbt6uSZ8ZaiD67XD9xvSz@kLoz2g1X9rQh6GZ8sOMRik3C5umCivduQ7IheEVwiMsHZOp0sblSB4P9ZaHPO9Yt/) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｇ↓→⁴⁰ψ
```

Draw an empty triangle of side 40. (Unfortunately Charcoal doesn't have a 1-byte shortcut for a triangle in this orientation.) The `y` variable is the null byte, which has a special meaning for the `Fill` function, in that it counts as a fillable area.

```
¤⭆⁸²⁰§-|﹪ΠＥ⊕ι∨λ±¹⊕ι
```

Calculate the first 820 factorials, negate them, reduce them modulo the incremented index, and index the results into the string `-|`. Use this to fill the triangle drawn above. (Charcoal's `Fill` works by painting the string across the region to be filled, rather than repeating it horizontally and vertically. See @ASCII-only's answer to [Bake a slice of Pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/93615/) for another example of how it works.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 73 bytes

```perl
say join($/,map$"x$_,1..40)=~s/./!$n++|(grep$n%$_==0,2..$n-1)?"-":"|"/ger
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIhKz8zT0NFXyc3sUBFqUIlXsdQT8/EQNO2rlhfT19RJU9bu0YjvSi1QCVPVSXe1tZAx0hPTyVP11DTXklXyUqpRkk/PbXo//9/@QUlmfl5xf91fctM9QwNAA)

```perl
say                         # print triangle string, say adds a \n at the end
join($/,map$"x$_,1..40) =~  # make multi-line triangle
                            # of $" (spaces) and $/ (newlines)
s/ /                        # replace spaces
  !$p++                     # count position, ! prevent first from becoming "|"
  |                         # bit-or instead of || or 'or'
  (grep $p%$_==0, 2..$p-1)  # check if $p position is a prime
  ? "-"                     # replace non-prime $p with -
  : "|"                     # replace prime $p with |
/ger                        # g=replace all, e=eval, r=return triangle to say
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 76 bytes

```julia
f(y=1)=1:40 .|>i->print.(y:(y+=i).|>j->"
-|"[j==y||2+(2==sum(j.%(1:j).<1))])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P02j0tZQ09bQysRAQa/GLlPXrqAoM69ET6PSSqNS2zZTEyiYpWunxKVboxSdZWtbWVNjpK1hZGtbXJqrkaWnqmFolaWpZ2OoqRmrCTRM8z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
Cḣ40mȯc¬ṗN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3/nhjsUmBrkn1icfWvNw53S///8B) (but you won't be able to easily view the output of non-printable characters) or [Try this online instead](https://tio.run/##ARoA5f9odXNr//9D4bijNDDhuYHIr3PCrOG5l07//w) to see the output switched to `0` and `1` characters.

Derived independently to [Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233634/95126), but it turns-out to use almost exactly the same approach...  Unfortunately [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk)'s prime-checker `ṗ` returns the index in the list of primes, rather than `1` or `0`, costing one extra byte.

```
    mȯ       # map over
         N   # the infinite list of integers:
      c      # character corresponding to
       ¬     # logical NOT of
        ṗ    # index in list of primes;
C            # now cut into substrings
 ḣ40         # with lengths of 1..40
```

Comment: I know it's been nearly a year since you've posted this. But `0`/`1` aren't allowed as output: "_You can use any **non-number** character in place of `-` and `|`._"

Comment: @KevinCruijssen - Well spotted.  An easy fix makes this even more similar to your approach...

Answer (score 0):

## [BBC BASIC](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 147 bytes

```
L=820
T=1
C=0
F.N=1TOL
IFFNF(N-1)^2MODN=0TH.P."-";:EL.P."|";:ENDIF
C+=1
IFC=T TH.
T+=1
C=0
P.';
ENDIF
N.N
END
DEF FNF(A)IFA=1ORA=0TH.=1
=A*FNF(A-1)
```

I won't lie, this is definitely not the best algorithm, but I did at least golf it down as much as I could.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 134 bytes

```
[]#n=[]
a#n=take n a:drop n a#(n+1)
main=putStrLn$foldl(\a b->a++'\n':b)"-"$["|-"!!fromEnum(0`elem`map(x`mod`)[2..x-1])|x<-[2..820]]#2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWN9uiY5XzbKNjuRKBVElidqpCnkKiVUpRfgGIoayRp22oyZWbmJlnW1BaElxS5JOnkpafk5KjEZOokKRrl6itrR6Tp26VpKmkq6QSrVSjq6SomFaUn-uaV5qrYZCQmpOam5CbWKBRkZCbn5KgGW2kp1ehaxirWVNhowviWBgZxMYqG0FcA3UUzHEA)