# Calculate the integer square root of a matrix

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, integer, matrix

Let \$A\$ be a square matrix that is at least \$2 \times 2\$ where each element is an integer. \$A^2 = A \times A\$ will then have the same dimensions as \$A\$, and will have integer elements. For example, let

$$A = \left[ \begin{matrix}
-3 &  2 \\
 0 & -1
\end{matrix} \right]$$

Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
A^2 & = \left[ \begin{matrix}
-3 &  2 \\
 0 & -1
\end{matrix} \right]^2 \\
& = \left[ \begin{matrix}
-3 &  2 \\
 0 & -1
\end{matrix} \right] \times \left[ \begin{matrix}
-3 &  2 \\
 0 & -1
\end{matrix} \right] \\
& = \left[ \begin{matrix}
-3 \times -3 + 2 \times 0 & -3 \times 2 + 2 \times -1 \\
0 \times -3 + -1 \times 0 & 0 \times 2 + -1 \times -1 \\
\end{matrix} \right] \\
& = \left[ \begin{matrix}
9 & -8 \\
0 &  1
\end{matrix} \right] 
\end{align}$$

---

Given an \$n \times n\$ matrix \$B\$ consisting only of integer elements, output any \$n \times n\$ integer matrix \$A\$ such that \$A^2 = B\$. You may optionally take \$n\$ as an input, and you may assume that you'll only have to handle matrices for which there exists such an \$A\$.

You may take input and output in any [convenient format and method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/66833). This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

<sub>The outputs given below are not necessarily the only valid outputs</sub>

```
[[8, 96], [-84, -40]] -> [[-8, -8], [7, -4]]
[[18, 63], [14, 67]] -> [[0, 9], [2, 7]]
[[9, 0], [-10, 25]] -> [[3, 0], [5, -5]]
[[25, -58, 57], [0, 7, -4], [0, -24, 31]] -> [[5, -7, 5], [0, -1, -1], [0, -6, 5]]
[[12, -33, 42], [16, 19, 20], [-90, 18, 63]] -> [[6, -3, 3], [2, 5, 1], [-6, 0, 9]]
[[33, -80, 86], [72, 57, -13], [-88, 40, 44]] -> [[-8, 7, -3], [-1, 0, 8], [8, 8, -2]]
[[88, 8, -72, 65], [-12, 45, 17, 33], [-27, 21, 36, 31], [5, 40, -53, 119]] -> [[-5, -4, 3, -9], [-6, 0, 0, 7], [-5, 5, -4, 7], [-6, 3, 5, -3]]
[[45, 39, -25, -17, 61], [29, 69, -15, 2, 45], [42, 51, 7, -28, 67], [27, 65, -25, 7, 25], [-66, -61, 9, 63, 1]] -> [[9, 7, -3, -9, 3], [3, -3, 5, -8, -2], [5, 3, 5, -9, 2], [3, -2, 2, -8, -4], [-5, -4, 0, 7, 6]]
[[150, -73, -37, -40, -43, 119], [-62, 191, 95, -87, -10, -88], [-31, -32, -64, 137, 82, -54], [22, -81, 32, 24, 46, -149], [-5, -16, -6, 42, 63, -23], [106, -160, -115, 25, 20, -5]] -> [[8, -8, -3, 5, 6, 3], [-7, 6, 8, 5, 6, -4], [5, 1, -1, -7, 1, -9], [0, 9, 6, -8, -2, 9], [4, 3, 2, -1, -3, -2], [7, -7, 2, -5, -4, 1]]
[[146, -37, -60, -38, 30, -8], [71, -42, -33, -26, -15, -55], [-39, -74, 2, -46, -19, 31], [42, -136, -46, 19, -41, -3], [61, 23, 12, -8, 37, -59], [-73, -13, 88, 90, -71, -11]] -> [[4, 7, -2, -4, 4, -1], [8, -1, -3, -6, 2, 4], [-9, 5, -2, 6, 1, 3], [-7, 6, 1, -5, 4, 3], [5, -8, -8, 2, 3, -4], [-8, -8, -1, -4, -6, -2]]
```

Comment: [Sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23732/66833). Brownie points for beating/matching my naive 16 byte brute force Jelly answer

Comment: will the input matrices be diagonalizable?

Comment: @Razetime Does that matter?

Comment: Really looking forward to answers in open source languages!

Comment: @Dudecoinheringaahing diagonalizable matrices can be eigendecomposed, which yields a relatively straightforward solution.

Comment: @Razetime I'd assume not, since e.g. `[[1, 2], [0, 1]] -> [[1, 1], [0, 1]]` but is not diagonalizable.

Comment: Suggest `[[5, 0], [0, 5]] -> [[2, 1], [1, -2]]`

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <sup><s>98</s></sup> 96 bytes

- -2 bytes thanks to [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler).

```hs
s a=[x|m<-[1..],x<-q(q[-m..m]a)a,a==[foldr1(z(+))$z(map.(*))r x|r<-x]]!!0
q=mapM.const
z=zipWith
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc69CsIwFAXgPU9xLQ6J@aERHITGJ9DJwSHc4WKVFpv@pBVL8d1ruzl@53DgFNS/HlU1zz2Q8@M3ZNpbY1CNme5453UwJiAJUuScfzZVHi2fuBRiO/FAreE7ISKM35jpEXGzSVnnlvxi7k3dD2xyU9neyqGYA5W1yxsGlOn4oPxcM2jfw3WI53rbF80HSMoE9AkSKVfz5ZJgsO5m761KUflUWUS2av@no4KlBK9tqmB/QPwB)

The relevant function is `s`, which takes as input a matrix `a` as a list of lists of integers and returns a square root of `a` in the same form.

The matrix multiplication part is taken almost verbatim from [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194216/82619) to [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100205/do-matrix-multiplication).

Comment: xnor's matmul is the pointfree form of `f y x = map (\xrow -> foldr1(zipWith(+)) (zipWith(\x yrow->map(x*)yrow)xrow y)) x`. `[foldr1(z(+))$z(map.(*))r x|r<-x]` is two bytes shorter.

Answer (score 7):

## [WolframLanguage (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/),  <s>54</s> <s>52</s> 45 bytes

```
Last@Solve[(q=s~Array~{#,#}).q==#2,Integers]&
```

–2 bytes from ovs.

–7 bytes due to reading the directions and realizing I can take *n* as an input.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLLSgNBELz7FQsBUZiRdM9jZw8BPQoeBI/BwyIhBoxisggS4q/Hqp4NGAPZMNPdVV1dPet@eF2s@2H10h@Ws8NDvx1unz7evhbzq8/Z9udus@m/f3YTN9lf33zOZhN19@/DYrnYbJ8vD4@b1ftwu5yr2@2Ka7q8d83Ol@gaH6f7/XNz8bdCUJIDSwQVuT0r6FwzNQaZukbTST4grwnECSypZRmKWnYaz17BGuQMJYpcCK6Jar2zawSdtLbqgByF/QcS4wvyxeZqlY0RklDHBCoiG@MJMtILpPDzhORUR8IxQr@AIVQCxVEF12y6EUqV0Sd0FulOeBN4SRA6jkonSJUNp4hlxgVxa8RopGCpJmkxx1lLVBo5WvOZYjJE@IxqUrH9SfNMHxOltTQlmO@8xlGpUSidJQXpi1nFmlIsHYRILiNjUUKOwluyBSqPhW7gwE1GCpJYqW1cU8g1VoVe61uaWmFmJ7H5@ZmL5yMYqam3@gBXgkm0BVNgPL4Wr3k01KdqkTnfRnPYV3ndcXMGE27SMkz4aAMzS1@VTtmQwFBBqqOZoYI/PprOLBYbxdQffgE)
[The request exceeded the 60 sec time limit, so it could only solve the first eight of the ten test cases.]

How it works:

```
q=s~Array~{#,#} //creates a dummy-indexed matrix with dimensions equal to *n* , calls it "q"
Solve[(q=s~Array~{#,#}).q==#2,Integers] //Solves q.q=#2 for q, where #2 is the input matrix, restricting the solutions to matrices with integer elements
Last@... //since there can be multiple solutions, this selects  the last one (the first ones contain conditionals)
```

Here I leaned heavily on the OP's allowance that output could be in "any convenient format", since the above code specifies the solution matrix in terms of its indexed elements, i.e., s[*row*, *column*].  For example:

[image]

For 3 additional bytes (48 total), a nicer output can be obtained with a small modification of the code offered by att in the comments:

```
(q=s~Array~{#,#})/.Last@Solve[q.q==#2,Integers]&
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like Mathematica doesn't like `ℤ` (the unicode character): https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773yexuMQhOD@nLDXasagosTK6WMclMzc1rzgzP6/YQTm2zjexpCizIiC/PLWozsjWVlnnUcuSWLX/AUWZeSUO6dHV1RY6CpZmtToK1boWJjoKuiYGtbWxClwIeUOgAjNjkAJDoLyZOZq0pY6CAVi3oYGOgpEpSPY/AA

Comment: Does `Last@Solve[(q=Array[s,Dimensions@#]).q==#,Integers]&` work for 52?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Yes, in this case it seems it's a special character specific to Mathematica.  How do Code Golf rules handle this?  Is it considered to be simply an alternate way Mathematica has of displaying `Integers` in its UI, and thus effectively equal in byte count to it?

Comment: @ovs Yes it does, thanks! I previously tried `Solve[q=Array[s,Dimensions@#].q==#, Integers]`, which doesn't work, but didn't think of adding the parentheses.   I'll update the post with your suggestion in a few hours.

Comment: @theorist I'm not entirely sure on the current defaults, but my personal opinion is that if there's no way to find out how many bytes Mathematica considers that to be, then you can't really claim it as your solution. The 54 byte one is fine tho :)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing  Makes sense to me.  I removed that latter section from the post, to clean things up.

Comment: `(q=s~Array~{#,#})/.Solve[q.q==#2,Integers]&` for 43 with nicer output. The fancy Z is just the REPL prettyprinting `Integers`.

Comment: `Print@@Characters@"Z"` (replacing the Z here with the symbol in question), for instance, yields `\!\(\*TemplateBox[{},"Integers"]\)`

Comment: @att I like what you did—getting rid of the replacement rules by actually making use of them, thus leaving only numbers, is very clever. But you still need to add `Last@`(adding 5 bytes for a total of 48), or some other modification, to ensure it provides only one soln for all input matrices. E.g., try `m3={{25,-58,57},{0,7,-4},{0,-24,31}};(q=s~Array~{#,#})/.Solve[q.q==#2,Integers]&@@{3,m3}.` [If more than one soln were acceptable, I could reduce mine to 45–5=40 bytes.] OTOH, if the Dude of many syllables :) required the output look like a conventional matrix, yours would be the way to go.

Comment: `#&@@` instead of `Last@` for -1

Comment: @att  Sorry, could you show me the complete syntax you had in mind with `#&@@`?  I assume you meant it to be used as a prefix version of `[[1]]`, i.e., `#&@@a` as a replacement for `a[[1]]`.  But while, for `m = {{25, -58, 57}, {0, 7, -4}, {0, -24, 31}} `,  `(q = s~Array~{#, #}) /. Solve[q . q == #2, Integers][[1]] & @@ {3, m}` does work, that's not the case for either `(q = s~Array~{#, #}) /. #&@@ Solve[q . q == #2, Integers] & @@ {3, m}` or`#&@@(q = s~Array~{#, #}) /. Solve[q . q == #2, Integers] & @@ {3, m} `.

Comment: Just a straightforward change to your current submission, `#&@@Solve[(q=s~Array~{#,#}).q==#2,Integers]&`. The first example fails because `&` has lower precedence than `#`, so `q` in `Solve` is taken to be a scalar; the second case only gets the first row of `q`.

Comment: @att  Ah, I see.  We were discussing your solution, so that was my focus.  But you switched from talking about your solution to mine. Yes, that will certainly work for mine, thanks!

Comment: How exactly does `#&@@` select last?

Comment: @Jonah  `#&@@` selects first, not last.  It applies the pure function `#&` to the list that follows.  MMA interprets `#&`as the first element of a list (because `#` means `#1`).  Consider:  `# & @@ {a, b, c}=>a;  #1 & @@ {a, b, c}=>a; #2 & @@ {a, b, c}=>b; #3 & @@ {a, b, c}=>c`

Comment: @theorist tyvm.  I think the part I was missing is that `@@` is essentially destructuring the list into args.

Comment: @Jonah Not saying you're wrong, but I don't think of it that way. Compare the result of using `@@` (`f@@{a,b,c}=>f[a,b,c]`) with  that of `/@` (`f/@{a, b, c}=>{f[a],f[b],f[c]}`). With `Apply` (`@@`), the list as a whole becomes the argument of `f`, while with `Map`, each individual element of the list becomes the argument of `f`.  Thus if anything, it’s `Map` that "destructures the list" into individual arguments.  I.e.,  the reason `#2&@@{a,b,c}=>b` is because the pure function `#&2` is being applied to the list as a whole,  not to individual elements of it.  It's the `#&2` function that....

Comment: ....extracts the individual element.  More precisely, according to the documentation, “`f@@expr` or `Apply[f,expr]` replaces the head of `expr` by `f`…`Apply` always effectively constructs a complete new expression and then evaluates it.”  By constrast, "`Map[f,expr]` or `f/@expr`
applies `f` to each element on the first level in `expr`."  Though they are similar in that, like with `Apply`, "`Map` always effectively constructs a complete new expression and then evaluates it."

Comment: @att  `#&@@Solve[(q=s~Array~{#, #}).q==#2,Integers]&@@{2, m2}` fails for `m2 = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}` (because of the way the output is ordered, taking the first part won't work in this case).  Thus I will need to revert to `Last@Solve[(q=s~Array~{#, #}).q==#2,Integers]&@@{2, m2}`

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
FAṀŒRṗLƲṁ€ðæ*2iị⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9qZWxsef//RkHhuYDFklLhuZdMxrLhuYHigqzDsMOmKjJp4buL4oG4////W1s5LCAtOF0sIFswLCAxXV0)

It's been over a week, so I figured I'd reveal my brute-force Jelly approach. This makes the following assumption, which I haven't managed to prove, but can't find a counter example:

> Let \$B\$ be the input \$n \times n\$ matrix, and \$A\$ be an \$n \times n\$ matrix such that \$A^2 = B\$
>
> Let \$b = \max\{|B_{ij}|, 1 \le i,j \le n\}\$ i.e. the largest absolute element of \$B\$. This answer assumes that, assuming \$A\$ exists, there is at least one matrix \$A\$ such that all its elements are in the inclusive range \$[-b, b]\$
>
> For example, for
> $$B = \left[ \begin{matrix} 9 & -8 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right]$$,
> \$b = 9\$ and there exists at least one \$A\$ such that all elements are between \$-9\$ and \$9\$ (the example in the question, for example)

### How it works

```
FAṀŒRṗLƲṁ€ðæ*2iị⁸ - Main link. Takes B on the left
F                 - Flatten B
 A                - Absolute values of each.
       Ʋ          - Last 4 links as a monad f(abs(flat(B)):
  Ṁ               -   Maximum
   ŒR             -   Bounced range; [-max, +max]
      L           -   Length i.e. number of elements of B
     ṗ            -   Powerset
         €        - Over each list:
        ṁ         -   Mold it like B
                    Call this list of matrices M
          ð       - Begin a new dyadic chain with M on the left and B on the right
           æ*2    - Matrix square of each matrix in M
              i   - Index of B in M
                ⁸ - Yield M
               ị  - Index back into M
```

One byte longer is a slightly more conventional way of extracting the root:

```
FAṀŒRṗLƲṁ€æ*2⁼ɗƇ⁸Ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUAAv/9qZWxsef//RkHhuYDFklLhuZdMxrLhuYHigqzDpioy4oG8yZfGh@KBuOG4ov///1tbOSwgLThdLCBbMCwgMV1d)

Here, the dyadic filter `æ*2⁼ɗƇ` means that it would save a byte over the dyadic chaining with the indexing. However, as we should only output one solution, and the `Ḣ` would chain to the filter without either `⁸` or `¹`, the indexing here actually saves a byte.

Comment: The reason why this is a byte longer than I [originally claimed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/233007/calculate-the-integer-square-root-of-a-matrix/233273#comment532225_233007) is because I forgot the `A` when I first created this

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>109</s> 100 bytes

```julia
I=Iterators
m%n=for i=I.countfrom(),j=I.product(fill(-i:i,n^2)...)
r=+m;r[:].=j;r^2==m&&return r end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BioMwFEX3@Yq3aUmYGIzjOLYh3fsNYkHaCBGTyPMJpT9vnSl0ec49cMd18r1@bFtjG3LYU8KFhUO0Q0LwtlG3tEYaMAUu5LjzjOm@3ogPfpp45s9exmshlFKCof0KBttzp@xo8FpYG45HdLRiBAQX7xu5hRbbslZDYSAH3UnWniCrP1DDqTK7KCEr8z@ha6i@DegSqt93ne@7zqH46VjHQj9zyi4z@khT5HRY/NNxkloI@f8mthc)

9 bytes golfed by MarcMush.

Boring bruteforce solution. Takes input as matrix `m` and its size `n`. But here's also a bonus:

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), <s>214</s> 194 bytes

```julia
~=round
m%n=.~filter(j->j≈.~j,1-2digits.(0:2^n-1,2,n).|>h->((t,z)=schur(m+0im);u=√t.*h;for i=n:-1:1,j=i+1:n a&k=a-u[i,k]*u[k,j];u[i,j]=reduce(&,t[i,j],i+1:j-1)/(u[i,i]+u[j,j])end;z)*u*z')[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVJLbqNAEN37FLVJBmyaofoHGOGLIEayYhKDbRJh2FgjrzNXmOPlIp5XHWkkEHRVvXofGJZzv88fj3s9vS/jYXV5Guv0/tqf526KBrUbvv58pvchYaUP/Vs/X9Mo2@pfo@JEJ2Oc/t4d1S6K5uQW19eX4zJFl03WX@Jqqb8@/87p@li9vk/U1@NW8ZaToe43vB1p/3yq92pp@uTUrpfmlAxtJaehrafusLx00XMyh3MigEFx/DOSgb7dLM2AetyNh@oWr5f17UfccPuYu@t8rZtVw6QryojbZNWUpIr/h4JKX6FgSdlMClyQNxWxJZ9/T2foc0batQmtGu1IuYJcLityoOSptCXDoc@alDFkwceeuCQt@BJ0sjiMoK2KjAoQ5xqbsN6IhoJsRtaGGRwKUmh7J/SarCPOycigzkkzGQ/KipyAlDPEXAYkBg0sik4APEZ0SR4VdiRrKmgjx6JdQxJ8YJ93AYHFQuc9bibAzHdK7MCRQ7YRx3i3gU9GNTxiFPgiDznBB@qGcSMKb4kBKvDqEJXGs4B2TUjMgoatbBGtwinSwKm0fIFM2h4LWZTjEp9BjQBFiTRNQSYLXzQHpf1OX2kf/CondiSO3MK8CoxlyE0mGRlKDSVlRXCFvEjDm8gkoXAiT5yzIXyTUnJgkdSu2tVl/xHNavcx9eN8HqOp25/TaH669rcOvz/HcZyEPzB@/AM)

This is an attempt at an algebraic solution making use of Julia's rich linear algebra library. In fact, Julia's `sqrt` or `√` already works on matrices, but obviously only returns the principal root which may not be the one we need. Therefore, we resort to [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#By_Schur_decomposition), and our task boils down to finding the square roots of the upper triangular matrix \$T\$ (notation is different from Wiki, but corresponds to Julia's):

\$M^\frac{1}{2}=ZT^\frac{1}{2}Z^{-1}\$

The square roots \$U\$ of matrix \$T\$ can be found by Björck-Hammarling method, which is what Julia itself uses in the implementation of `sqrt`:

\$U_{ii}=T_{ii}^\frac{1}{2}\$

\$U_{ij}=\frac{T_{ij} - \sum_{k=i+1}^{j-1} U_{ik}U_{kj}}{U_{ii}+U_{jj}}, j>i\$

In order to find all solutions, we also need to apply all possible permutations of the signs of the roots in the first equation. The upper triangle can then be fixed according to the second equation.

All these computations introduce some roundoff errors, but when checking for integers, we can resolve this by using inexact comparison operator `≈`. <s>There is a problem with zero, for which it behaves the same as exact equality and comparisons fail.</s> *(It works just fine when applied to entire matrix that has both zeros and non-zeros).*

The results are composed of complex numbers with zero imaginary part, so in TIO footer, we extract the real part for nicer display. It would be -2 bytes if it's acceptable to output the values without cleaning the roundoff errors, and further -3, if we can actually output all found integer solutions instead of just one.

Comment: [100 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY3BioMwFEX3@Yq3aUmYGIzjOLYh3fsNYkHaCBGTyPMJpT9vnSl0ec49cMd18r1@bFtjG3LYU8KFhUO0Q0LwtlG3tEYaMAUu5LjzjOm@3ogPfpp45s9exmshlFKCof0KBttzp@xo8FpYG45HdLRiBAQX7xu5hRbbslZDYSAH3UnWniCrP1DDqTK7KCEr8z@ha6i@DegSqt93ne@7zqH46VjHQj9zyi4z@khT5HRY/NNxkloI@f8mthc "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Comment: [95 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY3BioMwFEX3@Yq3aUmYGBLrOGrI7PsNYkGmKURMlOcTbH/eaWegy3POhTusY@jNtu/xkNxtQgjONHSffew3roUc3Jk89jThomacrusP8VsYR56FJsh0yYVSSjB0H9Fi23TKDRYvuXPxeERPKyZA8Om6k19ocS1rDeQWNJhOsraGrHpDBXVpn6KArNAvYSooTxZMAeXX/1o/u9GQf3asY7GfOWXfM4ZEY@J0WMLDc5JGCPn3JvZf "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online") counting up to `typemax(Int)` is probably enough. `-1%UInt` would be even shorter but it doesn't work because of negative numbers