# Err, Where am I?

Tags: code-golf

Oh no! I'm trapped in a big forest (Okay, not really, but just assume it) and I don't know where I am!

Thankfully, I brought my laptop. But when I searched 'Maps', It said 'No results', and I'm asking this as a last resort.

Please make a program which outputs my location's longitude and latitude in any two number format. `any two number format` includes:

- A tuple.
- A string including the longitude and the latitude.
- A JSON Object.
- etc..

Any API or Libraries may be used. That is, You can query Google Maps, etc. <sub>(I guess, They didn't trash their APIs :\)</sub>

Comment: PowerShell has `gl` for `Get-Location`, sadly I don't think `C:\Users\Connor` will help you escape the forest very much.

Comment: C:\Users\@Connor>sudo yes

Answer (score 74):

### Mathematica, 4 bytes

> Err, where am I?

```
Here
```

Evaluates to `GeoPosition[{latitude, longitude}]`.

Comment: o_O Mathematica had a builtin for this?

Comment: @SIGSEGV [Of course...](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44683/8478) (snippet #4)

Comment: Mathematica has a builtin for everything

Comment: this is pure gold

Comment: I read the challenge and briefly thought about a joke such as `print("You are here")`. Mwahahaha. And _just after that_, I scrolled down to your answer. :-)

Comment: Even better: the command `Sunset[Here] - Now` correctly returns the amount of time until sunset.

Comment: I'm amused to see an answer having this more votes than the question. Congrats 

Comment: @SIGSEGV I think you can already accept this... Cannot (ever) be beaten

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder There is `gl`(`Get-Location`) on Powershell but Connor is saying `gl`(`Good-Luck`) instead :\

Comment: :))(( @SIGSEGV This is sad

Comment: There's a `EasterSunday[year]` builtin, and if you're not christian, there's `EasterSundayGreekOrthodox[year]` just for you. I have no words.

Comment: @sagiksp Greek Orthodox is Christian. It's just a different branch of Christianity (with a different way of calculating Easter).

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Oh, I always thought it was a completely different religion, that's what you get for talking about christianity to a non christian haha. The builtin ridiculousness still stands though.

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>89</s> 82 bytes

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(x=>alert([(y=x.coords).latitude,y.longitude]))
```

[Try it online!](https://jsfiddle.net/MangaCoder/64wLmvjv/3/) (For some reason, this was not working in the snippet).

### Explanation

`navigator` object is a part of [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_Object_Model). `geolocation` is a property of its and is also an object, which contains geolocational data of the user. `watchPosition()` is a method of `geolocation` object. It takes in a callback function which is executed after the geolocational data has been retrieved. The callback function `x=>alert((y=x.coords).latitude+","+y.longitude)` is an anonymous (lambda) function that takes in an object `x` and `alert()`s the `latitude` and `longitude` properties of `x.coords` separated by a comma. Note that the object `x` is passed to the callback function by `watchPosition()` when the callback function is called (i.e. after the retrieval of the geolocational data).

---

**Note:** The geolocational data is GPS-based if GPS is available, otherwise it's based on IP.

Comment: `watchPosition` instead of `getCurrentPosition` saves 5 bytes. `alert([(y=x.coords).latitude,y.longitude])` saves 2 more

Comment: 1 character shorter, throws an error: ````for(f in r=navigator.geolocation)r=r[f](x=>alert((y=x.coords).latitude+","+y.longitude))````

Comment: It's a rare occasion indeed when JS can be competitive while relying on its overly long property names.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson Thanks! Implemented it!

Comment: @Shaggy True, indeed.

Answer (score 8):

## PowerShell, 130 Bytes

```
Add-Type -A System.Device;($a=[Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher]::new()).Start();for(;($b=$a|% Po*n|% L*)|% I*){}$b|select L*e
```

Ungolfed:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Device #Required to access System.Device.Location namespace
$GeoWatcher = New-Object System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher #Create the required object
$GeoWatcher.Start() #Begin resolving current locaton
whille ($GeoWatcher.Status -ne "Ready") do { sleep -Milliseconds 100 } #Wait for discovery.
$GeoWatcher.Position.Location | Select Latitude,Longitude #Select the relevent results.
```

Returns as:

```
PS C:\users\sweeneyc\Desktop> Add-Type -A System.Device;($a=[Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher]::new()).Start();for(;($b=$a|% Po*n|% L*)|% I*){}$b|select L*e

        Latitude         Longitude
        --------         ---------
53.4064177191653 -6.36202495701332
```

Turns out there is a way to do this, but it's not so pretty.

bonus: opens google maps on your current location.

```
Add-Type -A System.Device;($a=[Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher]::new()).Start();for(;($b=$a|% Po*n|% L*)|% I*){};saps "https://www.google.ie/maps/@$($b.Latitude),$($b.Longitude)z"
```

could save 3 bytes using `TryStart` but it outputs a `true` to the pipeline and costs more to suppress that.

```
Add-Type -A System.Device;($a=[Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher]::new()).TryStart($true,[int]9e8);$a|% Po*n|% L*|select L*e
```

---

## PowerShell (non-competing), 44 Bytes

```
(irm freegeoip.net/xml).Response|select *ude
```

Uses an external service since PowerShell has no internal builtins for 'current location' - this is IP-based Geolocation, so almost definitely won't return your actual location, it will return a 'default' location for your ISP, and if you run this over a VPN will present wherever the exit point is.

I've tried (not as a golf exercise) to get google maps API to work with the wireless-mac-address geolocation method, but it's far from accurate or golfable.

marked as non-competing due to the inaccuracy of the results.

```
PS C:\Users\sweeneyc> (irm freegeoip.net/xml).Response|select *ude
Latitude Longitude
-------- ---------
53.3472  -6.2439
```

this displays `Central Dublin, Ireland` when searched up, however i'm a bit outside the city center currently, about 8 miles from the returned point.

Comment: In C# the `GeoCoordinateWatcher` has a `TryStart` method which you could try which looks like it returns when the status is `Ready` instead of looping on it. If that method is available obviously.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder was the first thing I looked into, added in the example there, it only saves 3 bytes overall, but it dumps a `true` to the pipeline before I can output the lat/long, and I think it probably violates the spec when that's output.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder could feasibly save a byte(s) on the `[int]9e8` part when you set the timeout in `TryStart` but i can't get it to work with `9999999` and `[int]9e8` is the same as adding an extra 9.

Answer (score 8):

## Python with requests, <s>101</s> <s>100</s> 75 bytes

<sub>*4 bytes saved thanks to @КириллМалышев*</sub>

<sub>*21 bytes saved thanks to @Rod*</sub>

```python
from requests import*;print(get('http://su0.ru/auls').text.split(',')[5:7])
```

Comment: If this is Python 2, you can save 1 byte by removing the parenthesis

Comment: Maybe it's better to use a short url? For example, http://su0.ru/auls. So you will save 4 bytes.

Comment: You don't need all this formatting, `from requests import*;print(get('http://ip-api.com/json').text.split(',')[5:7])` should be enough

Comment: Link is broken! If you're going to use a URL shortener, best to use an established one.

Answer (score 2):

## [Angolf](http://github.com/XtremePlayzCODE/angled/blob/master/angolf.js), <strike>110</strike> 107 bytes

```
❦™navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition#x=>™alert##y=x.coords▷.latitude+","+y.longitude▷▷●
    ❦                                   Define an IIFE
       ™                                Get the scope
         navigator                      Get JavaScript's navigator object from the scope
             geolocation                Get the geolocation property of the navigator object
                 getCurrentPosition     Get the current position and execute a function
                     x=>                Define a function with x as a parameter
                         ™              Get the scope
                            alert       Call alert and alert the following string:
                         #y=x.coords▷ Define y with the value of the coordinates of x
                         latitude       Get y's latitude
                         +","           Append "," to the string
                         +y.longitude   Append the longitude to the string
    ●                                   Close the IIFE and call it with the scope
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! I can't seem to find any information about Angolf; would you mind linking its website?

Comment: https://github.com/XtremePlayzCODE/angled/blob/master/angolf.js, Sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 132 bytes

```c
_=>{var w=new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher();w.Start();var c=w.Position.Location;return c.Longitude+","+c.Latitude;};
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), <s>125 117</s> 96 bytes

This can only be tested locally, unfortunately.

```swift
import CoreLocation;var c=CLLocationManager().location!.coordinate;print(c.longitude,c.latitude)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA (Windows, Office 2016+ Only), <sub><s>278</s></sub> 272 Bytes

> Restricted to Windows, Office 2016+ for the use of the `Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1` provider

Full `sub`routine that takes no input and outputs [your current location](http://su0.ru/auls) as a `Excel.ListObject` typed table, including extra information.

```vb
Sub a
ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add"x","let S=Json.Document(Web.Contents(""su0.ru/auls""))in S
With Sheet1.ListObjects.Add(0,"OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=x",,,[A1]).QueryTable
.CommandText="SELECT * FROM [x]
.Refresh
End With
End Sub
```

Example output excluded for obvious reasons.

-2 Bytes for use of `[Sheet1]` over  `Sheets(1)`