# Split a list at the second occurrence of the first element

Tags: code-golf, string, array

Why should you golf in Haskell? [Find out here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10668/66833). In that answer, [Zgarb](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/32014/zgarb) defines a task:

> Let's define a function `f` that splits a list at the second occurrence of the first element, e.g. `[0,2,2,3,0,1,0,1] -> ([0,2,2,3],[0,1,0,1])`:

Alright then, lets!

You are to take a non-empty list consisting of digits, and output a **pair** of lists, clearly distinguished, such that the output is the input split before the second occurrence of the first element.

For example, you may output two strings of digits with a non-digit separator. The separator you choose between the elements of each pair and the pairs themselves must be distinct (e.g. space and newline), consistent and not contain digits.

The output must only contain **2** elements however. You may not output empty lists in the output.  If you choose to use newlines as a separator between pairs, you may not have a leading newline. You may have trailing newlines no matter what, and you may have trailing whitespace, so long as its sensible.

You may assume:

- The input will be provided in any [convenient method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), and you may output in any convenient method
- The input will either be a list of digits, or a string
- The input will only contain the integers `0` though to `9`
- The first element of the input will always occur at least twice
- The input will always have 3 or more elements in it

Additionally, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

### Test cases

```
[1, 1, 9] -> [[1], [1, 9]]
[4, 9, 4] -> [[4, 9], [4]]
[5, 7, 5, 5] -> [[5, 7], [5, 5]]
[8, 8, 0, 7] -> [[8], [8, 0, 7]]
[7, 1, 5, 7, 4, 2] -> [[7, 1, 5], [7, 4, 2]]
[0, 6, 9, 1, 1, 0, 2] -> [[0, 6, 9, 1, 1], [0, 2]]
[2, 9, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 9] -> [[2, 9, 3], [2, 4, 2, 5, 9]]
[0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1] -> [[0, 2, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1]]
[2, 7, 4, 6, 2, 6, 6, 4, 8, 2] -> [[2, 7, 4, 6], [2, 6, 6, 4, 8, 2]]
[8, 2, 2, 7, 5, 4, 7, 0, 8, 0, 7] -> [[8, 2, 2, 7, 5, 4, 7, 0], [8, 0, 7]]
[8, 7, 8, 9, 4, 2, 9, 4, 5, 7, 5, 1, 9] -> [[8, 7], [8, 9, 4, 2, 9, 4, 5, 7, 5, 1, 9]]
[3, 8, 1, 1, 7, 3, 6, 9, 7, 1, 4, 3, 4] -> [[3, 8, 1, 1, 7], [3, 6, 9, 7, 1, 4, 3, 4]]
[4, 7, 0, 5, 6, 5, 0, 1, 7, 8, 7, 8, 4, 1] -> [[4, 7, 0, 5, 6, 5, 0, 1, 7, 8, 7, 8], [4, 1]]
[2, 1, 8, 0, 3, 2, 2, 5, 7, 9, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 6, 9] -> [[2, 1, 8, 0, 3], [2, 2, 5, 7, 9, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 6, 9]]
[1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 0, 8, 6, 0, 3] -> [[1], [1, 4, 1, 2, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 0, 8, 6, 0, 3]]
[4, 3, 5, 2, 2, 0, 6, 4, 8, 6, 6, 6, 7, 3, 4, 8, 7, 6] -> [[4, 3, 5, 2, 2, 0, 6], [4, 8, 6, 6, 6, 7, 3, 4, 8, 7, 6]]
```

Comment: Brownie points for beating my quickly hacked together 8 byte Jelly answer :)

Comment: If I'm outputting each value as a single digit on its own line, can I use a separator that contains digits but is clearly distinct from the other values. Like [this](https://t.pxeger.com/xs.html?v=1<br>2<br>5<br>000000<br>1<br>5<br>1)?

Comment: The programming language that I use doesn't support a list of lists or strings so I can't really output two lists with a single function. Can I use two functions instead, each outputting one of the lists? Or is that not allowed? I also considered concatenating the digits into a single number mathematically, but the leading zeroes disappear.

Comment: @AidenChow You can output a single string with a clear separator between the parts (see Neil's Retina answer), does that work?

Comment: My language doesn't really support strings either :(. I guess I can't really do this challenge then.

Comment: @AidenChow If your language supports lists of integers, I believe that allowing people to output a flat list with `-1` as a "separator" shouldn't break the challenge (e.g. `[0,2,2,3,0,1,0,1] -> [0,2,2,3,-1,0,1,0,1]`), so you're welcome to use that format. Otherwise, I don't see how you could use that language here :(

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing [7 bytes, but not Jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229016/92951)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Yes that can work! Thanks for being flexible with your specifications regarding I/O.

Answer (score 11):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <strike>17</strike> 14 bytes

```
sub(FS$1,RS$1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/uDRJwy1YxVAnCEho/v9voWAEhOYKpgomQNJAwQKIzQE)

*Thanks to Pedro Maimere for the hint to lop off 3 bytes*

The interactions of the rules in the contest allow for pretty trivial AWK solution...  Assuming the input can be a blank delimited string of numbers, this will work.  If it has to include the brackets and commas (which I wasn't sure about from the linked article about convenient input), then it would be this instead.

```
sub(", "(a=substr($1,2)),"]\n["a)
```

And here's one in `><>` which might be shrinkable still...  It's the first time I've managed to get something to work in that language, so I wouldn't be surprised to learn there some trick I don't know yet.

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 41 bytes

```
i:o&0v
?(0:i<o$v?<=1:+{=&:&:;
 0+1o+19< ^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9MqX82gjMtew8Aq0yZfpczextbQSrvaVs1KzcqaS8FA2zBf29DSRiHu/38jYzNzQyNLYwsA)

I can add a more detail description if anyone is interested, but here's an overview of how it works.

The input it expects is a string of digits. Since the challenge specified that the list was made up of single digit numbers, I chose not to include a delimiter.  If that's a requirement, some additional stuff would have to be added...

The first line reads in the first number, uses it to set the register (for comparison as the rest of the list is read in), then pushes a counter that tracks the number of times the first number has been seen.  Then it passed control down to the next line.

```
i:o&0v
```

That line reads one digit at a time, starting with the second digit, and prints it.  There's a conditional code to add a `\n` when the counter hits `1` (meaning it found the second occurrence of the first digit).  The code is interpreted right to left to save characters.

```
?(0:i<o$v?<=1:+{=&:&:;
```

The last line is effectively like a "function" call to print a linefeed and tweak the counter so that it will never be called again.

```
0+1o+19< ^
```

Comment: FYI, the "doublepost" before happened when the StackExchange site was error'ing with a "We're doing maintenance" page for a few mins....  Sorry about that!

Comment: Neat approach! Using `FS` and `RS` uses 3 less bytes: `sub(FS$1,RS$1)` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/uDRJwy1YxVAnCEho/v9voWAEhOYKpgomQNJAwQKIzQE "AWK – Try It Online")

Comment: 3 fewer……..….:)

Answer (score 11):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 26 bytes

```hs
f(x:y)=([x],0)*>span(/=x)y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZTJTsMwEIbvfYo5cEiQK7I4ziKFOyceIPIhElRULaGiHNKnD/YsDVmgQrKiZub77d8zk76158Pr8TgMu6CvLmEdNL1VUXj/eD61XfBQ9@FleG/3HVQVPD1DEG7wrYaXjw3A6XPffcEd7KCJFbhVWthuoWliqzBUWjvFtIsp0Iz5N0/qOZYpyBW4Z8akD3gSQzO4UOBW5AmCC09KaAbn6JP2d8cnLOGwF0piJnSbGTRPN41G7STjd4hW5AkSqcvQ9uhBysVJr52mlx4SXCkaIBvxaIOT7EHSSyd0RYO0waWxhsnohxG2NIWW9aeDqWUaf0SLpqxSf3SqQKKggUEl/bjOxo95K3g8btGzI1LcnxqaY1WpkTQNGiMyqxPWn/ULvRx4qkaGeCaNo6vRU49NvI3j97Le1lhqnkqt6faluOMykPGx16OO231Lade@fY1PkmYoSkWdyDwYPmb6L/Ef5bK85C4R9jqnRlYu@1EFjR2@AQ)

Shortens [Zgarb's OG solution](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10668/20260)

```hs
f(x:y)|(a,b)<-span(/=x)y=(x:a,b)
```

by prepending `x` to the first element of `(a,b)` in a pointfree way, that is without explicitly binding `(a,b)`.

It would be nice it we could do `(x:)<$>(a,b)`, but that gives `(a,x:b)` -- the Functor instance of tuples lets us act on the second element but not the first.

However, Applicative lets us combine tuples as:

```hs
(p, f) <*> (a, b) = (p++a, f b)
([x], id) <*> (a, b) = (x:a, b)
```

It suffices to use `*>` which ignores `f` and leaves `b` unchanged.

```hs
((x:), 0) *> (a, b) = (x:a, b)
```

The `0` could be anything -- it doesn't matter. It would also work to use `>>` in place of `*>`.

**26 bytes**

```hs
f(x:y)=([x],y)>>=span(/=x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZTLboMwEEX3@YpZdAGSo/IwT4nsu@oHIC@Q2qhRUho1XZCvp/Y8Qg20USULhZlz7euZIW/d5fh6Oo3jPhjqa9gE7WDUNdztmsu564PHZgjH9@7QQ13D0zME4QbfGnj52ACcPw/9FzzAHtpYgV2Vge0W2jY2CkOVMT6mbUyBZsy9OVLPsUxBocA@MyZdwJEYmsGlArsiRxBcOlJCM7hAn7S/PT5hCYedUBIzod0sR/N002jSehm3Q7QiT5BIbYa2Rw9SLk46rZ9eekhwpWiAbMSTDU6yB0kvndAVc6RzXBprmEx@GGFLPrSsPx1MLdP4I1o0ZZX6o1MlEiUNDCrpx202fsxbyeNxj54dkeL@1NACq0qNpGnQGJFZ9Vh31i/0cuCpGhnimTSOrkZPPTXxPo7fy3pbY6l5KrWm21fijstAxqdeTzpu9z2lWfv2NT5JmqEoFXUi85DzMf6/xH@Uy/KSu0TY25zmsgrZjyqYm/Eb)

A alternative, this time using the Monad instance and `(>>=) :: Monoid a => (a, a0) -> (a0 -> (a, b)) -> (a, b)`

**27 bytes**

```hs
f(x:y)=([x],[])<>span(/=x)y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZTJbsIwEIbvfYo59JBIps3iLCDg1EsPVR8g8iESRY0KCQIO8PSpPQtplhZVsiIy8/3275kJn@Xp62O3a6v9oTme4aU8l09vTd1UG/C85dr32613WVz9lVdcjCqMv1yfDmXtPa8u/rXdl1UNiwW8voPnP@DbCjbNA8DhWNVneIQtFKECu@YGZjMoitAoDM2N6WPaxhRoxtybI/UQSxRkCuwzYdIFHImhAZwrsCtwBMG5IyU0gDP0Sfvb4yOWcNgJJTEQ2s1SNE83DTptL@N2CCbkERKxzdD26EHKxUmn7afHHiJcMRogG2Fng5PsQdJjJ3TFFOkUl8YaRp0fRthSHxrXnw6mlmn8EYyaMkn90akciZwGBpX04zYbP@Yt5/G4Rw@OiHF/amiGVaVG0jRojMis9lh31i/0eOCpGgniiTSOrkZP3TXxPo7fy3RbQ6l5LLWm28/FHZeBjHe97nTc7ntKM/Xta3ySNEFRLOpI5iHlY/r/Ev9RjstL7iJhb3OayspkP6pgatpv)

Using `<>` to do concatenate elementwise `(a, b) <> (c, d) = (a++c, b++d)`. This is available in Prelude without an import starting in version 8.4.1.

Answer (score 11):

## Vim, 3 bytes/keystrokes

```
*O<esc>
```

Jump to next occurrence of word and make a new line.

---

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 2 bytes

```
*O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/X8v//39DLiMuYy5DLksgNgQA)

Since V has implicit escape after `O` (?), we can use just 2 bytes.

---

Old (general) 8-byter:

```
Y/<C-r>"<BS><CR>O<esc>
```

---

Input is each list item on a single line. Output is two lists separated by a blank line.

Uses vim notation for the keystrokes (`<C-r>` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, *etc.*; see `:help key-notation`).

Explanation:

- `Y` yank the first line
- `/<C-r>"<BS><CR>` search for the next occurrence by inserting the yanked text into a search `/`. Yanking into the search register with `"/Y` doesn't work (`:help quote/`). The backspace deletes the line-ending, which is yanked. (Alternately, use `y$/<C-r>"<CR>`.)
- `O<esc>` new blank line above.

This generalizes to any type of list as long as each element is a single line.

---

I don't think we can use POSIX vi for this, since I don't think it has `<C-r>` to insert registers. It doesn't have the search register `"/`, but that doesn't end up mattering.

Comment: Don't golf often, so not sure how to link/format the header in this case

Comment: Is `*` command helpful?

Comment: @tsh doh! I was trying to be too general!

Comment: since the question requires the element to be inside the split, I think `*i<cr>` should be correct.

Comment: @Razetime thanks ; somehow I missed that.

Comment: Nice answer! You can use [V on TIO](https://tio.run/##K/v/X8vfJrU42e7/f0MuIy5jLkMuSyA2BAA) since V is more or less a superset of Vim.

Comment: @user yeah, I’n aware of V, but havent dug into it enough to really know how to golf in it. It handles somethings differently (the bracketed escape is to stand for a single-byte: the escape key/character). Thanks though

Comment: Yeah, there's certainly a few differences - V uses `|` instead of `0` and stuff like that - but it's very handy if you want to link to a Vim answer online :)

Answer (score 8):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>18</s> 7 bytes

```
Ṙṫ:‟€vp
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E1%B9%98%E1%B9%AB%3A%E2%80%9F%E2%82%ACvp&inputs=%5B7%2C%201%2C%205%2C%207%2C%204%2C%202%5D%20&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
œṡḢ©®;Ɱ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVC7DcIwEO2ZwgO4iL9JxChRShqUBWhpGIAJoENCSHTQghiELGLs93wgpJN9d37v7j2vV9O0Sem1f98P79vxcXpclvP1kp67eXtOaRiMVjn6US8Gn2@tfEmDVq1W@Qyl6rTK0eReqVowiMgUW3r5LYLNcU1tW/RcrggFra8Ei3BAk2Mqh4Mj3iPCQ4GtYsikQI@k@VPYodfRDrBMvq7EsQOKmltooQta9Oj4@jXcEgAJIpprePqfASNynIjl6l6GVg3cV0hGNhqBBwCdMKyYjBxcVXGWlffvV0WJVmZQZxzHDw)

```
œṡḢ©®;Ɱ  Main Link
œṡ       Split at the first occurence of
  Ḣ      The first element (pops the element)
   ©     (also copies that element to the register)
      Ɱ  For each block
    ®;   Prepend the register
```

As pointed out by Nick Kennedy in the comments (full credit to them), `Ḣ;Ɱœṡ@¥` also works and is slightly more functionally pure (though `Ḣ` still modifies the list itself, so it's not entirely pure):

```
Ḣ;Ɱœṡ@¥  Main Link
Ḣ        Cut off and return the first element
      ¥  Last two as a dyad (for chaining; this makes the right argument the modified list for both inner dyads rather than applying consecutively)
 ;Ɱ      Prepend the first element to each of
   œṡ@   The modified list, split at the first occurrence of the first element
```

Comment: Nice. `Ḣ;Ɱœṡ@¥` is another 7 that doesn’t use the register (the functional programmer in me likes links that leave the environment unmodified, though of course `Ḣ` does actually modify the argument to the link).

Comment: @NickKennedy Ooh, nice. I was trying to figure out how to get that working but the register trick was easier for me to find and I forgot to keep trying to find the right chaining pattern, lol.

Answer (score 7):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```
[ dup first 1 pick index-from cut ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVTBTsMwDL33K8wHDG1pkhaQdkVcuCBOiMPUZVI11pW2k0BVvr3YTkOSsYlFTRO/59h5drfbVMOxm15fnp4f72HT98eqh73pGvMBvfk8maYyPbSdGYbvtqubAR6ybMwAfyOscNyBhRtYrHFLBsszGe1MkriTMUkyPLLRkxQU@KiYRibLbxURSxxLRn6JJdO82RMLTIOOkCBisjNbXjnIOyxBY2J0pWXqEgDLu9hJIJLjTEepVAsHWV4FOEQTOHJ8r/hJ4jnIRfNwiEiJa3xrHBLvLdKoDnZxY0pQUDBLIVLg4Rf0TAmX1C1xV3JhBc@ufmfdUM4VvEb0h@XIIHkLXJHUVCOJ66RrAsny7pwY2o1yVogrVq6Yc5WpyNdorjFTwVd8/ZxlofzvOKi7hT4vuie7AlxzsNEXROEEt3nOd6FAVBY9n/Pn6/rPIUhBQQWjrg80j4K96L46lSSmOyEuu9jMTm@wPbWwq7t@wHTautpD3WzN12LXHQ9QnQZ4n0bkHjbtmv9W4Hb6AQ)

### Explanation:

- `dup` Duplicate the input.

  **Stack:** (e.g.) `{ 0 2 2 3 0 1 0 1 } { 0 2 2 3 0 1 0 1 }`
- `first` Get first element.

  **Stack:** `{ 0 2 2 3 0 1 0 1 } 0`
- `1` Push `1`.

  **Stack:** `{ 0 2 2 3 0 1 0 1 } 0 1`
- `pick` Put a copy of the object third from the top on top of the stack.

  **Stack:** `{ 0 2 2 3 0 1 0 1 } 0 1 { 0 2 2 3 0 1 0 1 }`
- `index-from` Find the index of `0` starting from index `1` in the sequence on top of the stack.

  **Stack:** `{ 0 2 2 3 0 1 0 1 } 4`
- `cut` Split a sequence in two at an index.

  **Stack:** `{ 0 2 2 3 } { 0 1 0 1 }`

Answer (score 7):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 11 bytes

```
{(2#*=x)_x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU/LCgIxDLzvVwS8qCBs0zbtCn6Lt/Ug7HlB/PY6maiEtnlMZqbPy/bYxlivr6Mezrf9dN/fY5WEWKZViiw4SKo0nOppR8wokTbAfFJEvZzFgPfdORqKMuP2eUVOjCIy3sRDlDMYXkMU0GvoKEcVrQbsX7Xj6TSmvMNbCv6MkTtoyNyNWyzI@YsgqhhUircvV/kZSVTJVHbahbtBbiGQSJgIqBhmQpQGjcsU8i1lO75kjEa4i5pM4wM)

- `(...)_x` [cut](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cut/) the input (`x`) at...

  - `2#*=x` the indices of the first two occurrences of the first value in the input

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 41 bytes

```python
lambda l:[l[:(i:=l.index(l[0],1))],l[i:]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZTbboJAEIbvfYq5A5JtwxkkoS@CXFhdIilVAjSxNT47XeagpTWamg3uDvPP/rP7hfZz2B32Qdp2Y5Wvxmb9/rpdQ5MVTZHZdZY3z/V@q492U7il8hynVE1RZ2U5DrofesjBLjwFZixLBUVo/hWE0zRSkCgwz2hapQrMcE1sWiWooAwj8aeYeRejmsq5HPYxFpgVpaJsyQIfR4DZpPFYQ4VjfB/jCNGBz2ZISQZDnLgzhynGUmoHc2ly6Uo6DjCLPCfohbqgFkOMhHw0tEuEKZGYpm3oGV4b8MROIGZp66UUZQ@03yTyZEdP0iNMDEThS5MxFWZXVMuX95ejimUkUoN8xqWz0MdWbwa9xfsvPN5@WU4ThABr0zLiI0UUMJLyCeNhY4SBYDYQCYzPoJBLp1cMBh/XDzREyHCwSvAQLQPC8jkiZPImJH@cp1dg7qKCyTNYmJ5buMgxPgCGL/Da1BUa7usRNiiU6/sPOuLwNzxs6S4@hp/NTm/edDfhY60@/CTcWApw5gWWs6gOHQxKQ72Hr7q18VOjQKBzsgWY3/TxqezBwUXb1fvBrqzTcIanFzj1ZzjxJoXO8748W874DQ)

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
^((.).*?)\2
$1¶$2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY27DcJQEATzq8NINoF1t/ePCGkCIQgISAgQtbkAGjOPeGdn3o/P83XfD/P5tl/neV3W42m5gCb5bhP2ib7bLtJkbeTpTlWclOJpII4WYRBaYfAmBpSFhZAWiLACFZBuyf9fZbWhbZiGU0skNTrF1GggHs6SA7JhkGIFPNt0wNEkYgJ3VVNwBSuNBeBRiYhUq4wf) Link is to test suite that double-spaces the output for convenience. Takes input as a string of digits. Explanation: Simply finds the earliest next match of the first character and inserts a newline before it. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @Jakque.

Comment: Found an odd same score [solution](https://tio.run/##FY07bgIBDER7n2OJFoqVPf5LRClzCQooKNKkiHI2DsDFFlNNMW/e/N3/f35v@2H9vu7r1/lz3Y7b6XiR7UTPx/KxLxO7SJO1kac7VXFSiqeBOFqEQWiFwZsYUBYWQlogwgpUQLolv3eV1Ya2MY1TSyQ1OsXUaBAPZ8mBbAxSrIBnmw4cTSImcFc1BVew0jQAz0tEpFplvAA) which uses that the first match found ltr using a lookbehind is the one we want. Couldn't get it shorter, but figured it may provide some inspiration.

Comment: Can't you use `^` instead of ```1` ```at the start of your regex to ensure it will be only one replacement? I could save 1 byte

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman's I actually started with that approach, and had juggled things around (e.g. ``1`(?<=(.).*)\1`` -> `¶$1`) before ending up with what I have now.

Comment: @Jakque It was a legacy of my original approach, but obviously it's entirely unnecessary now, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 31 bytes

Thanks [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime) for -1 byte.

```javascript
a=>a.match(/^(.).*?(?=\1)|.+/g)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDbSsNAEH33R7pRTOc@u0jsj4iwxPSibVOaIgj@e4yvMr6eM3Nu7/WzTv31cLk9TpfD23A9jeeP4WvednPtnmt7qrd@n9avqW3a@03adC/YfLcP610z9@N5Go9Dexx3aZtWiGXVNE93f2ApEsHqqhGeM3iEO6oLRQxYQYSQosIkpGEuIGJAwPDPxchMcqiaiVzF4Z@k2XMRKrI0jBfhjOhsxVE43GbRVlNAX6QkDogZmEi9CC8uFvogCpIqszBBNuDQi5UIlqpm5izZ7fdq/gE)

Comment: since `.+` will greedily match anything, is the `$` needed?

Comment: @Razetime it works.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>17</sup> 16 bytes

```
(]{.,<@;@}.)<;.1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NWKr9XRsHKwdavU0baz1DP9rcvk56SkYahuq1ehl6lXrcaUmZ@QrpCkY6BgBobGOgY4hCMOEDXVAyBLGNVGwVDD5DwA)

In a sentence:

*Cut on first element and then meld together the tail elements.*

Consider `f 0 2 2 3 0 1 0 1`

- `<;.1` Cut using the first element as the fret:

  ```
  ┌───────┬───┬───┐
  │0 2 2 3│0 1│0 1│
  └───────┴───┴───┘
  ```
- `{.,<@;@}.` First element of that result `{.` catted with tail of that result
  `}.`, razed `;` and then reboxed `<@`.

  ```
  ┌───────┬───────┐
  │0 2 2 3│0 1 0 1│
  └───────┴───────┘
  ```

Answer (score 5):

## **[BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/)**, <strike>12</strike> 11 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
⊢⊔˜·∨`·»⊑=«
```

[Try it here.](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oqi4oqUy5zCt+KIqGDCt8K74oqRPcKrCgpGwqjin6gyLDcsNCw2LDIsNiw2LDQsOCwy4p+p4oC/IjI3NDYyNjY0ODIi)

Explanation:

```
⊢⊔˜·∨`·»⊑=«   # tacit function which can take input as either a list or a string
          «   # the input list shifted left
         =    # equality comparison with
        ⊑     # the first element of the input
      ·»      # shift the result right
   ·∨`        # 'or' scan
⊢⊔˜           # group the input according to those values
```

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>38</s> <s>37</s> 36 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to pajonk, as well as outputting the right-way-around now, and then -1 byte thanks to digEmAll*

```r
function(l)by(l,cumsum(l==l[1])>1,c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVTbasMwDH3fVxj2UBtciBPnUrb2R7o@dGGBQpqWpoWNsW/PbEluKi9bGTUhSOdIx0dKT0OzHJpLV593h0626vVDtrq@7PvLXrbLZbs2G7UyulZD3277Q/P2PL@i39Xn8bTrzrJxr@qp3p7l7KXzv5n6eiC8rKXRwp2FUuJRzFdi7WpqsfahzeYGZl1ACzvCfMAjLYPlWpRauGc@In3MI32UgSst3ElcegRXHklRBi5BJ9Z3vdORQhlPpBwjukoFiMebJozLkr5CEtNTSGcujLVBw41dlPdchog1pHAyEIAyDJNBedJAiFgJ3q8AaAHHgocp00MoksRwsf/YFUdm4SWZGsok8LdJVZCucGGAhi/X3eD7VtF63CGwFhnUx4GW4CpOEVfBQuRmVxnc95omxAuPbuSAzcPg8Gr4tGyI9xnwvUyM1QTPs2A0Xn0RpJEHqJrNeqTSuO@QWWsTbm8CLwdGFqhp2IcCe/z8l/gHObYXpaUBeF3SIpwyFEP7CmZ1zCZv/@I7AcM3)

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##lVTBasMwDL3vKwy7JOBB7DhOekh/JOQwwgoFtx1L8/2ZLcl15WULAxOC9J70/KTka53d@3w7ffTrablO9/PtWrhy/nTne@HktFzm5VK4vneDGsujKiO8mAolhT@HshSv4u0oBo@QYgihcXxJMOMDUpgEC4GANAzWSNFK4Z9NQoZYQIYoA3dS@FP5dAJ3AUlRBm5BJ9b3vXWiUCYQKceIvpIF8XjTinFZMlSocrqGdO3DWBs0PNlF@cBliFyDhlODAJShmAzKkwZC5ErwfhagFo4BDzXTQyiSxHC5/9gVR2bgpdoayibwt0l1kO5wYYCGL4/d4PvW0XrsEFiLGurjQFtwFaeIq2Ag8rSrDB56bRPyhUc3GsA2cXB4NXwaNsR9BnwvG2NV0fM6Go1XP0Rp5AGqZrNOVBr3Dpm1VvH2KvIaYNSRquM@WOzx8y/xD3JuL0rTEfhYUhtPG4uhfZZZnbPJ27/4XsD6DQ "R – Try It Online")?

Comment: @pajonk - Yes!  Thanks!  How did I miss that?

Comment: And it doesn't output in reverse order anymore after the edit.

Comment: @pajonk - Ah - even better, and I didn't even notice before!  Thanks a second time!

Comment: [-1 with by()](https://tio.run/##lVTbasMwDH3fVxj2UBtciBPnUrb2R7o@dGGBQpqWpoWNsW/PbEluKi9bGTUhSOdIx0dKT0OzHJpLV593h0626vVDtrq@7PvLXrbLZbs2G7UyulZD3277Q/P2PL@i39Xn8bTrzrJxr@qp3p7l7KXzv5n6eiC8rKXRwp2FUuJRzFdi7WpqsfahzeYGZl1ACzvCfMAjLYPlWpRauGc@In3MI32UgSst3ElcegRXHklRBi5BJ9Z3vdORQhlPpBwjukoFiMebJozLkr5CEtNTSGcujLVBw41dlPdchog1pHAyEIAyDJNBedJAiFgJ3q8AaAHHgocp00MoksRwsf/YFUdm4SWZGsok8LdJVZCucGGAhi/X3eD7VtF63CGwFhnUx4GW4CpOEVfBQuRmVxnc95omxAuPbuSAzcPg8Gr4tGyI9xnwvUyM1QTPs2A0Xn0RpJEHqJrNeqTSuO@QWWsTbm8CLwdGFqhp2IcCe/z8l/gHObYXpaUBeF3SIpwyFEP7CmZ1zCZv/@I7AcM3 "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @digEmAll - That's very nice, and I never would have thought of it.  Would you like to post it yourself as a (currently) winning R answer?

Comment: @DominicVanEssen: wouldn't be fair, the main idea is yours, I simply changed split function with one similar ;)

Comment: @digEmAll - Well, thanks very much, then!  Updated.

Answer (score 4):

## Scala, <s>35</s> 30 bytes

Saved 5 bytes thanks to @cubic lettuce!

```scala
x=>x splitAt x.indexOf(x(0),1)
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/b01x62e7QQKGLtfD6dbEQw)

Hopefully, I'm not FGITW'ing this.

Comment: You can save 5 bytes via `x=>x splitAt x.indexOf(x(0),1)`

Answer (score 4):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 35 bytes

```sh
shift>$1
ls
for x
(rm $x&&od;<<<$x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqJgoGAEhMZA2hCE/xdnZKaV2KkYcuUUc6XlFylUcGkU5SqoVKip5adY29jYqFRo/v8PAA)

Explanation:

- `>$1`: create a file named the first input item
- `shift`: shift the input array, removing the first item
- `ls`: list the directory. Since we created `$1`, this prints the first item
- `for x`: for each item `$x` in the input array: `(`

  - `rm $x`: try to remove the item. If the item `$x` is the same as the first input, and the item has not already been removed, this will succeed
  - `&&`: if that succeeds:

    - `od`: print `0000000` as a separator
  - `<<<$x`: print the item

With some loose interpretation of what is allowed as a separator, we could have:

### [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 33 bytes

```sh
shift>$1
ls
for x
rm -v $x||<<<$x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqJgoGAEhMZA2hCE/xdnZKaV2KkYcuUUc6XlFylUcBXlKuiWKahU1NTY2NioVPz/DwA)

- `rm -v` is `v`erbose; if the removal is successful, a message `removing 'x'` is printed which is arguably a separator, as well as printing the item
- `||`: if that fails:

  - `<<<$x`: print the item. We only need to do this if removal fails, because `rm -v` prints the item already

Answer (score 4):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>49</strike> 46 bytes

```
func[x][reduce[take/part x find next x x/1 x]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVTLbtswEDybX7H1WYGtpxUD9kf0SvBASDQSxJYESSkUFP12l/ugFaVNjACEQO7M7pA7FHtXX3@6GrSBU9vur6fXptKT0b2rXyunR/viNp3tR5jg9NzU0LgJ59MmhsmYa2UHN@zht1rpOAI/Hg08HEHr2ESgaW08lvlJBJlguEI4IyyPYBeB/@YCYwBhCiGjjMCPLYaZUSIcQsjYkTZX8tUT4UkY2QFAtk8raEO85e2csEAwbRtyEgqnfsmFSC0cVkBMWMKiltBISYoF41lQQFELsGjytguiFDQyakYyKwtFxJck6R5LcJczmmz/ael/WR/7XFK4ZDeJzpObh@9uQCk23mNj3ZSKsh076hTbwAZmFAm3Z8FFgU/Ycu/4sDlx8uAAH4K/2ezGfTpd23f@xKGPaegfH@4x7ENOyVucTZvzxLd7meb2h2X0ZX5OzDSkJMHYQmov/8XvZEr3eB9JINyuVhHGLhThBhVzJz@mSuu@TDbqj1IPxz1c/LsDbfcD8D0CPcGb0W9wOOAj5R8epbr@uRlBq5U9n@Hc2hp6151t5TYYoGcJqvZysbBeq9XaV3S2GWB8siMgY3TDKLQn@8tBZ4fB1Wtlrn8B)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 26 bytes

```
g[b_,a___,b_,c___]=b.a|b.c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVBLboMwEN1zCh/ASvEHOywqcYTuowgZVKVZpIuKHfXZ3ckbXiqNzHh4v/GjbF@fj7Ld19La7bLMtszzbOW7yvf6vpzK73Ja28fP/Xt7m27TNHX77qyRGqux3R6lsSZWaQdrsjVyDs/b2RqpXmbAZXAUIhxfrel2@ZvAV8Wec49hkKuCQRxJ8agAvLIcLDzFEwAJFRFDZc/kasyIpv/PeWAyJiOttXkt55gkAKbJM/LoLrppxCTyjdRoAGZgcjXSMz63OHZ3jBQYWN1Hyh4x1BEsR1NH/ABkIMVz06TKDKZqnoDXiyVWpohGTbWa1v4A)

-10 bytes thanks to @att

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##RVA7bsMwDN19Ch2AQKx/PBTwEXoDQzGKNEM6FN4Enl1lSL8UIGSKfj/q2Y7vr2c7Hnsb477220Zt2zaS7y5f/uj9Ro1Jzp15fP4@fo7Ler@sU@@enNTCjqaepCGXWNpMrpKTM79uV3JSs8wUV5VjEOEEJjd1@VuUb4oz5kGHUa4GVuICStCKijeWV4sA8aKAopU0hslewbWYSZv5P@eJqTpZYG3NezmPJFFhlrxqHtvFNk06SXgjM8qKyUhuRnam1xbn7h6RIgKb@wLZM4Y5KsvD1AOfFRlBCdi0mDKCmVoA4P1iBVUhYlELsxvjDw)

Comment: or [26](https://tio.run/##RVBLboMwEN1zCh/ASvEHOywqcYTuowgZVKVZpIuKHfXZ3ckbXiqNzHh4v/GjbF@fj7Ld19La7bLMtszzbOW7yvf6vpzK73Ja28fP/Xt7m27TNHX77qyRGqux3R6lsSZWaQdrsjVyDs/b2RqpXmbAZXAUIhxfrel2@ZvAV8Wec49hkKuCQRxJ8agAvLIcLDzFEwAJFRFDZc/kasyIpv/PeWAyJiOttXkt55gkAKbJM/LoLrppxCTyjdRoAGZgcjXSMz63OHZ3jBQYWN1Hyh4x1BEsR1NH/ABkIMVz06TKDKZqnoDXiyVWpohGTbWa1v4A) with a more generous I/O interpretation

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 56 bytes

```hs
f(h:t)=(h#t)[h]
(h#(x:y))a|x==h=(a,x:y)|0<1=(h#y)$a++[x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZTbaoNAEIbvfYqB5kLJBjysR@oD9KoPIF4IbTAkTUvrhYG8u92dQ6yHNhQW0Znv3/13ZpK2@Tq@nk7DsHfbovNKt33ovKqtHfPi9sXF85prX5Zt6TbKfl79x8BCF2/TbLdVXw9vzeEMRQFPz@B6Dn6V8PLuAHx8Hs4dbGAPVaDArLxej8JuB1UV1ApDeT3DtIkp0IzZL0vqORYrSBWYZ8ykDVgSQzM4U2CWbwmCM0tKaAan6JP2N8eHLOGwFUpiJjSbJWiebuqP2knG7uCvyEMkIpOh7dGDlIuTVjtNLz2EuCI0QDaC0QYn2YOkl07oignSCS6NNQxHP4ywpSm0rD8dTC3T@OIvmrJK/dGpDImMBgaV9HKbjR/zlvF43KNnR0S4PzU0xapSI2kaNEZkViesPesXejnwVI0Y8VgaR1ejpx6beB/H38t6WwOpeSS1ptvn4o7LQMbHXo86bvc95epvX@OTpDGKIlGHMg8JHzP9l/iPcllechcKe5vTRFYq@1EFk3r4Bg)

Because why not?

### flawr's suggestion, 33 bytes

```hs
f(x:y)|(a,b)<-break(==x)y=(x:a,b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZTJboMwEIbveYo59ACSkViMWVQeoKc@AOJA1ESNsrRKe0ikvju1ZwnF0EaVLBRmvt/@PTPktf/Ybw6HYdgGl/oafgW9WoeP0fq86fdB01zCa2MTLjgc@90J6hqeniEIV/jWwMvbCuD9vDt9wgNsoU0U2FV1y1GIImjbpFMYqjoP0zamQDPm3hypfSxXUCiwz5xJF3Akhjy4VGBX7AiCS0dKyIML9En72@NTlnDYCSXhCe1mBs3TTeNRO8m4HeIFeYpEZjO0PXqQcnHSaafpuYcUV4YGyEYy2uAke5D03Ald0SBtcGmsYTr6YYQtTaF5/elgapnGH/GsKYvUH50qkShpYFBJP26z8WPeSh6Pe7R3RIb7U0MLrCo1kqZBY0RmdcK6s36h5wNP1cgRz6VxdDV66rGJ93H8XpbbmkjNM6k13b4Sd1wGMj72etRxu@8pF799jU@S5ijKRJ3KPBg@Zvov8R/lvLzkLhX2NqdGViH7UQVNN3wD)

This is based on Zgarb's solution (`f(x:y)|(a,b)<-span(/=x)y=(x:a,b)`).

Comment: fyi @zgarb's original version was `f(x:y)|(a,b)<-span(/=x)y=(x:a,b)` :)

Comment: @flawr I know, hence the "Because why not?" :P This is the shortest I could get without stealing Zgarb's solution :/

Comment: ah sorry:) then I misunderstood. I mean you could still use `f(x:y)|(a,b)<-break(==x)y=(x:a,b)` :P

Comment: @flawr Feels a bit like cheating to me...let's do it!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

```javascript
a=>[a,a.splice(a.indexOf(a[0],1))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVTbboMwDH3fV@QRpKwlEC596H5hH4B4iChMnRBUY5r29yyxY2iatNWkCCH7HPvk2PCpftTcfp0v36/jdOqW/rio41utuNrNl@HcdpHancdT9/veR6pOGi7iuFnaaZynodsN00fUR7XgTJ9DE8dsv2esrkXDWQ2h5uUGK3WUM7lhTcDApY/NOSs50898g5uYgUPUY1Sc6ZMYzMqoDJyiHqME7dhJS0k3ns0YNuU8tq5ZwIXQgsQp4CRNmSRYIwVMpnPYBdRcmWnzpoCLCKlJ4WQgBQUJR5DNWzWECGnCOxeAL@BIMDd1lFmUFefiQtPB/jhVCS9JaGRB4MM5VoCpcLuAiy/rDrkbWtk1ekbw@mTQBMddgtM4Y9wWCZGr7XbgpuEdQug7QXNyIOQ0UbwkPqUz3ecM@MzuzVvQHDIyH504kEhrCep3lmCj2j14Rvb6CzJDEDkHWkb8lBalsI28f81/yCG3UWRK6HWPCzolVUQ3C8f5W7a1@iG/Wf4A)

Comment: I am not quite sure... Is "return first part from modify parameter in-place, return second part from return value" allowed by this question? `a=>a.splice(a.indexOf(a[0],1))`

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>60</s> 57 bytes

```powershell
$a,$b=$args
$r=(,$a),$y
$b|%{$r[$r[1]-or$_-eq$a]+=,$_}
$r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PUzLCsJAELvvV8whiuIutD5aL/MlspStbH1QXJ0eRGq/fZ1eJCEkIeSZ3lGGa@x7d04SMzoeM4JFywhyGQyEVxZhbfExaL@LEXJSlt4lQePiC8Fv2KKZdJono0pMS3S0px0daKsoqNJ0VJ1Raz@nmirj7un20LvC/23p8w8)

It takes the input as an array of ints, returns two arrays

#### Another approach for 59 bytes

```powershell
param($a)$a[0..(($i=$a|% i*f $a[0] 1)-1)],$a[$i..$a.Length]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxBDsIgEADvvGLTrIYaIaVF2gs/8AeGw8aAxdTSoIkH9e1YL95m5jBLevp8H/00iXPKvmCwr7JQphtHqpFOjZScY7RI7w3EXYBfc6BqoWq3XwWjlEjy6OfLY3TlwxhmsLDFAJXuDm3bGD0YY/pOD72pmLimOGNeJ39UrnwB)

Takes the input as a string, returns two arrays

Comment: The `$y` is always empty in the 2nd line

Comment: @mazzy Yes this is on purpose, I needed something null, shorter than `$null` or `@()`

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 67 bytes

```
func[b][collect[keep/only take/part b find next b b/1 keep/only b]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVFLboUwDNxzitHbV0BIAnTRQ3QbpRKfoD49CohSqT09tQ0KLRGRY49nJvEa@v019M4nwzP24WvqXOtdN49j6Db3CGFJ52n8wdY8Qro064YWw33qMYVvjts0x4Vqvd@HeQ1N947x/rnBJaDP5chR@yPWqKHP2KCEgTlPFSpkKM9TST1c11BnJoOlXubKYk5RpoBiFKHriFS0CsIxNo9YZrNUsbQ0qamozHj2omnP/vmoKFOxZyjZD8/XfQqqsqeS9Ngf@9YU63hfZjRUM@KH2fjXf3zloliIC@avhUFUmNNfr0hdgjFULwSlxK/l/qjIvUoqxz2trFI6WN36xLtlvU80oY957I9h3Z5e3lIiuEFyg2Rpor8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 45 bytes

```python
i=input()
a=i.index(i[0],1)
print i[:a],i[a:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBCsMgFAX3nsKdWh5Fk7TQgCf5/IUkQv7GSLGQnt6mYRYDA1O/bdvL0Jd9zdEY0yVKqZ9mnUpR7lLWfFghzwhO1beUpoXmxBBKM/fzUPnIi/3/Tt/02Ckg4MWK/OkBIzwmPPC8ygX/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ćk>Ig‚£
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SHu2nWf6o4ZZhxb//x9toGMEhMY6BjqGIBwLAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##PU87CsJAFLyKpH5F9p802niLkEJBRCwsBCGdlfaWtt5EPEkuEmcmIo/dfZ95M7On82Z72E2XYVUtxttjUa2G9fS5H5fDfrw@36/Jpq5z5qztrYvWWsSbrFiyhKyxxmoryAow7EfzqGrLwHKvVu1RBfOcAtUK4REBc2KcMNzO6GZEBLOXAnHUi7jrv16DqqEf87pnT7PPgAm1C/jpg94i8qg/kCWhn6RNFp748@CkEKRKzlabYiYXME5sTvOEWRDCy1vmrlS449Wd/5IVRWgq5r7/Ag).

**7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) alternative provided by *@ovs*:**

```
ćk>°RÅ¡
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SHu23aENQYdbDy38/z/aQMcICI11DHQMQTgWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##PU@7DcJAFFsFpX5F7p800DABbZQCJApEQYGExABAzwZswAyBSVgk2A5CT3f3Pn6273Bcb3bb8XReVLPP9T6rFufl@L7t58Nz9boMj9HGrnPmrO2ti9ZaxJusWLKErLHGaivICjDsR/OoasvAcq9W7VEF85wC1QrhEQFzYpww3M7oZkQEs5cCcdSLuOu/XoOqoR/zuidPk8@ACbUL@OmD3iLyqD@QJaGfpE0Wnvjz4KQQpErOVptiJhcwTmxO84RZEMLLW@auVLjj1Z3@khVFaCrmvv8C).

**Explanation:**

```python
ć       # Extract head of the (implicit) input-list; pop and push remainder-list and
        # first item separated to the stack
 k      # Get the first 0-based index of this item in the remainder-list
  >     # Increase it by 1 to make it a 1-based index
   Ig   # Get the length of the input-list
     ‚  # Pair them together
      £ # And split the (implicit) input-list into parts of that size
        # (after which the result is output implicitly as result)

ćk>     # Same as above
   °    # Pop and push 10 to the power this 1-based index
    R   # Reverse it, so we have a 1 with some leading 0s
     Å¡ # Split the (implicit) input-list at the truthy indices (or singular index in
        # this case: the 1)
        # (after which the result is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: [`ćk>°RÅ¡`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SHu23aENQYdbDy38/z/aQMcICI11DHQMQTgWAA) is another 7 byter.

Comment: @ovs Ah nice! My original 8-byter was using `Å¡` as well, but I had something along the lines of [`āsćkÌQÅ¡`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SGPxkfbswz2Bh1sPLfz/P9pAxwgIjXUMdAxBOBYA) instead. I'll add yours as an alternative to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `ṡ`, 5 bytes

```
hẆḢḣf
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=%E1%B9%A1&code=h%E1%BA%86%E1%B8%A2%E1%B8%A3f&inputs=%5B7%2C%201%2C%205%2C%207%2C%204%2C%202%2C%207%2C%203%2C%209%2C%204%2C%202%2C%207%5D%20&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
h      # Get the first element of the list
 Ẇ     # Split list on head, without removing it from the list
  Ḣḣ   # Get the first element from the resulting list
    f  # Flatten the rest of the resulting list
       # 'ṡ' flag - print both lists, separated by a space
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

Feels like there should be a shorter way for this, but can't seem to find it right now.

Selecting the right-hand element ensures we don't select the first letter itself, the check on the incremented variable ensures we only split once.

```js
óÏ¦UÎªT°
ó        // Split the input string between char pairs where it's not true that
 Ï       // the right-hand element
  ¦      // is different than
   UÎ    // the first char of the input
     ª   // or
      T° // T, initially equals zero, plus plus.
```

[Try it here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=88+mVc6qVLA=&input=IjI3NDYyNjY0ODIi)

Comment: I can't seem to do better than 8, either.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 54 bytes

```javascript
x=>[x[s="slice"](0,i=x[s](1).indexOf(x[0])+1),x[s](i)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvu/wtYuuiK62FapOCczOVUpVsNAJ9MWKBCrYaipl5mXklrhn6ZREW0Qq6ltqKkDlsjUjP1fUJSZV6LhFezvp1dcAmSnZ6ZVaqRpRBvoKBjqKBjpKIAYsZqamly4VBqCVRoSUgYx0ACk5j8A)

Comment: Note that you should split *before* not *at* the element, so the output should contain the same digits at the input, but as two lists (`[0,1,0] -> [[0,1],[0]]`)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Ah, didn't notice that. That actually saves two bytes!

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB/Octave, 63 bytes

```matlab
function y=f(x)
l=find(x==x(1));y={x(1:l(2)-1),x(l(2):end)};end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVHLisMwDLznK3yrDS7EjzhJg79k6WGpEzCUtOx2S8rSb09dqerJ3tsaYYQ1Go3Gp8Pl8zqu6/QzHy7xNLObn/giqqOf4hz44v3ClRDDzf@mZHfkWmyVkAt/ZrtxDuI@pHsN8RrD@OU32/89m6Ga@IeSLEW/F1WI32f@Gi6eJZveJbO5UiNZK1m6m1y1kyxFnTC5agsTkSGN0DlM6nUwHeXVBZgGjElVpALavkCoIQywIacqcKIwB3gHYWEjXVgWmdEQC0n9pwMdYDq0F3oxebta@hEDXehJC7ugS2iphRdb@EpU1UBLQyagDLxt2RBF6xhaFqX2NPSlGfXkSBQpVNTeQKMhBk2mORxU2AJnacK/v8ZRtMSJe7m9WB8)
Outputs cell aray with 2 cells, which hold appropriate vectors. I've chosen such output because rules say 2 lists must be distinguished, not necessarily be separate variables. And outputting 2 variables turned out to give a little longer code.

Ungolfed/explained:

```matlab
function y = f(x)
l = find( x==x(1) );   % indices of elements equal to first element
l2 = l(2);             % index of second occurence
y = { x(1:(l2-1)),...  % vector containing elements before 2nd occurence
      x(l2:end) };     % vector containing elements from 2nd occurence
end
```

---

Interestingly, it's also possible to create anonymous function that does the same, but it's 2 bytes longer:

```matlab
@(x){x(1:find(x(2:end)==x(1),1)),x(find(x(2:end)==x(1),1)+1:end)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVHLasMwELznK3SLRFWwHpbtBEP/o@QQaht8cUpTgqH0293tTjYnqbeaRcj7mJkdXd4@z7dx2170ar5W7Q7TvAx61f4wLoPpe0oZ64yxq85Xnhz/f29Tf16ux90w3@Zh/Oj3z//77Y@7Sb86qyi6kyHe67u@k5vfUqS8VTFXqq1qrKKzzlVbqygq6slVG2YEAlH4XA/NJmaHvKrQ5rknUBVQDNsVAD1HYDRgugImhCXuTxyRN/KFZYEMQyJfqj8daLmnhb08i8vD1dKLBJ6CJw3vApdgaeRMLDwlVNU8UosJkIEzlg1xsk6QZSG1E9K7ZujJgThR6GS85sEgCF5MSyAqbAEuL/2Pp0kSjWBir3Qy2w8)
It is possible to shorten it more as [flawr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24877/flawr) noticed, resulting in **42 bytes** but it's an **Octave-only** solution, not working for MATLAB:

```matlab
@(x){x(1:(l=find(x==x(1))(2))-1),x(l:end)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVFNa8MwDL33V@RWC1yIP5O0GPY/Rg9lSSBQ0rGOEhj97akmVT3Zuy0I41jSe09Pl4/v021Y1ze1wM@izF6d0zjNvVpSwl8AZQF2BvSizvth7uG@juk0Xw@bfrpN/fCVtrv//baHzajeja4wuiMg7/VTPcnhN@XxXVc@lwq6anSFZ8hlW11h1FiTyzbEyAhIYXM12BuJneXVhTJLNQ6zDEWwXQHQUjhCY0xTwGRhkeojhaeJbGFYRmZDPF3qPx1oqaZle6mXLy9XSxtx1MWeNDQLu8SWenrxhVWyqkAtQUxgGXz6siFGxnEyLEvthPSpmfXkQIwoNNIeqNEJghXTIhMVpmAuK/Wv1USJRjB5rniE9QE)

Comment: Actually you can shorten the anonymous function to `f=@(x){x(1:(l=find(x==x(1))(2))-1),x(l:end)}` - in Octave assignments are expressions too!

Comment: @flawr sadly, this doesn't work in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
τÄ∩T╕(û▒(Ç
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=e78eef54b82896b12880&i=%5B1,+1,+9%5D%0A%5B4,+9,+4%5D%0A%5B5,+7,+5,+5%5D%0A%5B8,+8,+0,+7%5D%0A%5B7,+1,+5,+7,+4,+2%5D%0A%5B0,+6,+9,+1,+1,+0,+2%5D%0A%5B2,+9,+3,+2,+4,+2,+5,+9%5D%0A%5B0,+2,+2,+3,+0,+1,+0,+1%5D%0A%5B2,+7,+4,+6,+2,+6,+6,+4,+8,+2%5D%0A%5B8,+2,+2,+7,+5,+4,+7,+0,+8,+0,+7%5D%0A%5B8,+7,+8,+9,+4,+2,+9,+4,+5,+7,+5,+1,+9%5D%0A%5B3,+8,+1,+1,+7,+3,+6,+9,+7,+1,+4,+3,+4%5D%0A%5B4,+7,+0,+5,+6,+5,+0,+1,+7,+8,+7,+8,+4,+1%5D%0A%5B2,+1,+8,+0,+3,+2,+2,+5,+7,+9,+4,+3,+5,+1,+9,+6,+9%5D%0A%5B1,+1,+4,+1,+2,+5,+5,+3,+3,+4,+3,+2,+0,+8,+6,+0,+3%5D%0A%5B4,+3,+5,+2,+2,+0,+6,+4,+8,+6,+6,+6,+7,+3,+4,+8,+7,+6%5D%0A&m=2)

annoyingly long, but i guess it works.

#### [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)(regex)

```
êt┴≈∟·M╤\+6)
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8874c1f71cfa4dd15c2b3629&i=%22119%22%0A%22494%22%0A%225755%22%0A%228807%22%0A%22715742%22%0A%220691102%22%0A%2229324259%22%0A%2202230101%22%0A%222746266482%22%0A%2282275470807%22%0A%228789429457519%22%0A%223811736971434%22%0A%2247056501787841%22%0A%2221803225794351969%22%0A%2211412553343208603%22%0A%22435220648666734876%22&m=2)

#### [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 22 bytes(tsh's regex)

```
"^(.).*?(?=\1)|.+$"|Fm
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%22%5E%28.%29.*%3F%28%3F%3D%5C1%29%7C.%2B%24%22%7CFm&i=%22119%22%0A%22494%22%0A%225755%22%0A%228807%22%0A%22715742%22%0A%220691102%22%0A%2229324259%22%0A%2202230101%22%0A%222746266482%22%0A%2282275470807%22%0A%228789429457519%22%0A%223811736971434%22%0A%2247056501787841%22%0A%2221803225794351969%22%0A%2211412553343208603%22%0A%22435220648666734876%22&m=2)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 12 bytes

```
Fȯ:;:←¹↕≠←¹t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3@3Eeitrq0dtEw7tfNQ29VHnAjCz5P///9GmOuY6pjqmsQA)

no split at index builtin, but `↕` (span) helps a bit.

it's similar to xnor(and Zgarb)'s answer, but argument destructuring and functors don't exits, so it just uses a fold.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
ḣ$£¥€ƛ¥p
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E1%B8%A3%24%C2%A3%C2%A5%E2%82%AC%C6%9B%C2%A5p&inputs=%5B7%2C%201%2C%205%2C%207%2C%204%2C%202%5D%20&header=&footer=)

This is possible in 8 bytes Imao

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 21 bytes

```
<0o{oa.0*3+)3l=}:{::i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38Ygvzo/Uc9Ay1hb0zjHttaq2soq8/9/Ix0Fcx0FEx0FMx0FIzBpBuZaALkA)

Takes input as a list of characters (though you are free to put whatever you want in-between digits). Managed to reuse my check that we're not splitting on the first input with the jump quite nicely.

#### Explanation

```
<                      Go left from the start
                  ::i   Get the input and duplicate it twice
              =}:{      Compare it with the first character of the input
           )3l          Check if this is not the first char
        *3+             Add these checks together and multiply by 3
                        This will be 3 if the digit is not the same, or if it is the first digit, otherwise 6
      .0                Jump to that point on the first line
   {oa                  If it is the split point, print a newline and clear the first digit
  o                     Print the current digit
 0                      Push a zero to increase the stack height for the first digit check
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 bytes ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit prefix function

```apl
⊢⊂⍨1,⊃<\⍤=1↓⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVC7SsRQEO33K@YDdMl9J6CVjbaupc2CRIRAli2EZdlGIUUgiw8sbawsBBvdwtL9k/mReGYSmZs7rzPnzM18UR1ereZVfd3vd9w8rLn7waHh@8YRt8H1Sou6WpU3VUVlvaRbk6aGuHlClE@znts3bu@4ezcH3N4fXe53x4abZ5T7ErzcbVHm7oO7r99Px80jb19m5ye4L07PZn1JBlZMSvJUkIcPlPAFRDkso4QoASN1TxZZRhFYmcs0t8gcbnSBKhRhYQ5eMEYxMh3hI8yD2aqC1U5AJQH5r5cjy2Uf5fbjTsOeDh3RTohkD9nNI/b6BmEJqAfVTiOTH3cwquBUVTgLnVRm4ZoMfwNo7Qf0nCKs7hZlVlVkxmp1eEtUS4oWxfgH)

`⊢` the argument

`1↓` drop first element

`⊃`…  apply the following tacit infix function to that, with the first element of the argument as left argument:

`⍤=` Boolean mask indicating where they are equal

`<\` cumulative right-associative less-than scan (effectively zeroes any one after the first one)

`1,` prepend a one

`⊢⊂⍨` use that to partition the argument, starting a new segment on every 1

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.8, 40 chars

If outputting a list of two strings is allowed...

```python
lambda s:[s[:(i:=s.find(s[0],1))],s[i:]]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>58</s> 57 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

Takes input as a string. Outputs to STDOUT.

```c
l;f(char*s){l=index(s+1,*s)-s;printf("%.*s %s",l,s,s+l);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZLbjqMwDIavy1NYSJWgZUZxzll2nqTlYkRpF6lLRw1ajVTx7F0nHIaZK/v/jJ0/wfXLpa6fz2t5zuo/7/edzx/Xt7Y7NZ@Z32NB@sWXH/e2689Zun3dedj6tLgWvvD7a14Oz3@39gSXrL51vocwAna@gLVsPj@aum9OefJINsso/@vYpQX4vEw25yyGuXbstv7YxfLSWyZDklAZ/r63XRZHrc/oG9/7Q3XgFbwB1TaPFNHRgBSB4lBEJJ0MSDqQM1JGqcCUAUomaC0zAVoIyQQNKiN5wJRBSKcC0w6RxUpMgS0l7gSXXEUjlMMo5j7OBUOGsZFyiGLuNFJzraWNc4OCSc4eOTdKGjZbneTasTXWSe4k3XF8C2tgTabPhEU0QjuDUsT3iQAWMj@eYUorhobGymh6TUB@WUfLBOfKOCnoGD3ePkD4RqfPESVypYSQgjOrmZj@2k862xCKc0YvobU2Qlqjo5WRwhoPyWagraL1ut0hC7vT0nKwksJvQE1xv89p5iUbt6etDqwqYBFYha17/gc)

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##XZLbbqMwEIavw1OMIlUyCVn5fFi2b9A3SLiIaJJFYkkVo@1KEa9eOtjBpXvl@b@fGY@HqXd1e@wu47hpyzPZ@Pz@dmu6/kzWTz82rYen1q8L0j6/177@fSN@ywr8KN/5whdtXg7j32vzChdSXzvfA2bCxhewUKd/b6e6P73m2T1bpdqt/3no1gX4vMxWZxKO2Tx0aB@64KfsMhuybCr459h0JBRbXNKffO/31Z5X8Axore4va8YcFsATMBiKCKWTAUoHMkFllApUGcBoxtZSE7CFKZqxYcpIHgwMYYpni2rHGI1eiIF@mdwJLrmKTaGAqFIu54IyymIyCggqZRupudbSxuqThIdO/XJulDQ0tf3Q37q3xjrJncQ3P@ZjDSzR/KGwjBmhnWFSxJkFAgmlkRqqtKLMYGkZ218ikItHMEsF58o4KfAu/ZjFROEbnhMYk4wrJYQUnFpNxfxH/8epGaE4pzgWrbUR0hodG4oYlnzIVgNuHa7f9QZkWqMGl4eWePwCpvHcbnOseiFxu5pqT6sCkmDVtJTjR31ujxc/7t4/AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 69 bytes (on-calc) / 104 bytes (as text)

```
Ans→A
2→I
While ⌊A(I)≠⌊A(1
I+1→I
End
Disp seq(⌊A(J),J,1,I-1
seq(⌊A(J),J,I,dim(⌊A
```

### Explanation

- `Ans→A`: The program stores a list in `⌊A` from `Ans` by calling it like this: `{list}:prgmL`
- `2→I`: Initialize `I` with 2
- `While ⌊A(I)≠⌊A(1`: While the current element is not equal to the first

  - `I+1→I`: Increment `I`
- `End`
- `Disp seq(⌊A(J),J,1,I-1`: Display the first chunk of the list
- `seq(⌊A(J),J,I,dim(⌊A`: Implicitly display the second chunk of the list

### Earlier overcomplicated solution, 78 bytes (on-calc) / 130 bytes (as text)

```
Ans→A
Ans=Ans(1:Ansseq(I,I,1,dim(Ans→B
SortD(⌊B
⌊B(sum(Ans>0)-1
Disp seq(⌊A(I),I,1,Ans-1
seq(⌊A(I),I,Ans,dim(⌊A
```

Comment: As TI-BASIC uses a tokenised encoding, I think you can just count this as 69 bytes and get rid of the text count. Additionally, you have a typo in your explanation ("Set `I` to 1" but it has `2`)

Comment: Alright, thanks for pointing that out lol

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 112 bytes

```
((({})<>)<>){{}({}<(({})<>)<>>)({<({}[()]<({}[()])>)>()}{}<>)<>({}<<>({}<>)>)}{}((()()()()()){})<>{}{({}<>)<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzNCoNADITfZU/JQdifVldYAj6H9KC9KIUeeg377OmsVkpCJjN8zPpZ9ve2PF9mRKSVi7RVrTDlnwiTFriZ@HEpCwtxBdeIxp8XcUvRx9fw0aNV6Ufjmlk3mfMhphzHNNz7OObgUx5uGerh8Ef3BQ)

Comment: I don't think this correct, based on the TIO output. The split should happen before the second `0`, so both lines would start with `0`. Looks like you're splitting one place to early. Also, it looks like the first `1` is being turned into a `0`?

Comment: @Dudecoinheringaahing Whoops.  I posted the wrong version.  That version did something very odd.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 66 bytes

```c
k;f(d,l)int*d;{k=printf(" %d"+(!l||d[l]-f(d,l)),k=d[--l])-1?-1:k;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/LboMwEDzjr3CRWkEBCYOxQ0nUD6EcIlAiHqVRQk8J305nF1pVK@z17MzsUEfnul6Wvjh5TTj47Ti9NsW9P1yuaE@eK58bN/CehsejKYcqWll@2B@aMoqGyo/Ue6Te@mJePo/t6Pl3AZ2cyiSuCnH6ukqP3u0hLtq9MkUbBL68C4fAoRDOrT6O2IIl4cvgA/iTdJDIbj/g2DT/yVPQEdv5jclY2VUEzsK5fE83z3XZ0JtCdl6xj5HQWcxLKhUqF6nUMpdaaJlJiy9Dt0PF0goDRDGuZSIsMAMu6WK8dzLBK8WJKVi5IFWCSnETRwlFAMkNboMi80QoRRePMkDkvG5UKRqLL2dTOtdYFBVDGtN@i46yUD6NXgulN6MMg4wD2M1LUxALO8VbUt5Mtjlr2ZzciKTYUDEhk7RQs4ACGhILtdtUCcPrLxkuy3Raan4A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 44 bytes

```clj
#(split-at(inc(.indexOf(rest %)(first %)))%)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVTbaoNAEH33KwZKYAVTvKyXUOgv9AMWH0qiYBGTGAv5ezs7s2PW9BIKy0bnnLnsOWv2/fHjc2xmdWhaaOcndTn13bR9n1Q37NVzNxya61urxuYywSZUbTfSQxhuwjkM1OF4ac5g4GoCk0SAa1fDy/YVjEnqCAwF6sBo/I1AC2ZfLawtlkdQRoB7LrCNWJhiyKgiwBXbqGNUFpYYMkrqzZWweCo8F7dsQZCNWQUNxCPHXsIKsmmxy0kpmuEb16Fuy2EdahPWOHdLaWXUihsmXkOHum6Cc0@euiBGQUuTGKnX2XFc8zWL1eMOrLKmh/i7pD/S7nSuKFqxm8Tmh8VD/wZUzsZHdKybUVG2oySl2AX2T1NkuT0rsm3wC53vHR82J0ouDvAheNeeG4/5dG1v/iSiYyby8dl2MoY7JE/omXZLdL49Sq3lC9O0Mz0nYiYZqRhbuNJ33@J/Ulk9HiMVfLlZhaxSarA@hafkfa6T7s/sOsClTmM3TP0AqoUr/tfMXw)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 18 bytes

```
i:vi
=?\o:i:@
oa<^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9OqLJPL1j4m3yrTyoErP9Em7v9/Ix0Fcx0FEx0FMx0FIzBpBuZaALkA)

Saves a copy of the first character `x` at the bottom of the stack, compares the read character to that, and then prints a line feed and enters an infinite `io` loop when it finds the second instance of `x`.

This was a nice instance of being able to use the 2D-ness of `><>` by reusing the singular `o` for both a horizontal and a vertical loop.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>47</s> <s>42</s> <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```powershell
$args-split"(?<=.)(?=$("$args"[0]))",2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLbTsMwDH3vV0RToa20ocRxbhITSLwigdgjQghGgaFyWzvxAPv2kdhdVehDbJ/jy6mTj/evet0@102zyx/FXHzv8rv1UztrP5pVNylPjudHVXkyz8sJ4ZNreVNVkynstll2WmbTslAqFFNRKDpCUSUMA6YQiUHGjDMmhcbRaRj1XlLs6Yg@oU4Zh5Cg6JGJETHSBqUkUeSS03MQNCAYGhp9MhRzJYCWSvYVQDTFXOvQgrXoqXWKyDLCSgGcQSf3gvvwj27vfEAIGP@Vt@I5dwRSnvZKOW2DU6hpUwSQswd5j04aa6RysTGS8jFC8V6/8lIDGBdQxzGWl5BAcsZExbeGCozRGjVIbzmN7/A/wUq0AZBxG9Zap9E72k@PkjtiqiyrxI84EN@ZiF/erNpuGk39mMx69fTcxaeW3zK7rttNk4DD@AIpl/Dry8XZpu3eXy/uX@pld3PKzdK32CyXddumHlwcX6WY1Z88Qszu3h4GRvUMTR06nKe8cfnAXO3VDfUDVRzPxXmUVyR60LnNtrtf)

Comment: Looks like you can remove the `$z=` bit: [Try it online!](https://bit.ly/3vSrwU1 "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks. No, the operator `-match` returns a boolean value as result. The `$z=` catches this boolean value and does not return from the function

Comment: Thanks angain. I've found another solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 41 bytes

```python
def f(a):a.insert(a[1:].index(a[0])+1,-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNI1HTKlEvM684tahEIzHa0CoWyElJrQCyDWI1tQ11dA01/ycq2CpEm@goGOsomOooGIGRgY6CmY4CUNACzIAgc7AaiCCQbRbLBbKAq6AoMw9ouuZ/AA)

Another Python approach using the allowed flexible output format. Not any shorter than the existing solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
CiḢ$Ṭk
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVC7FcIwDOyZwgWli/if1IyRl5ICyAK0NOxBnQGgZpKwiLHvrPB4T8@W5DvpzufjPF9zPpzW52O/vpZLft8/tyXncTRalRgmvRt9ubXyNQ1aJa3KGWrVa1WiK71aJTCIKBRbe@Utgs1xXWtb9FypCAVtaASLcECTYxqHgyPeI8JDgW1iyKRAj6T7U9ij19MOsEw2V@LYAUXNCVroghY9Or59DbcEQIKI5hqe/mfAiBwnYrl6kKFNA/dVkpGNRuABQCcMKyYjBzdVnGXlffuqKJFkBnXGafoC)

Took me embarrassingly long to realize that `œṖ` splits before, but `k` splits after...

```
C         Subtract each element from 1, creating a new list object.
  Ḣ       Remove its first element and then
 i $      find its first index in that list.
    Ṭ     Create an array containing a 1 at that index,
     k    and split the original array after that 1.
```

With no mutation at all:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
Ḋiḷ/Ṭk
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVA5DsIwEOx5hR9gifhO3hKlpADyAVoaJN6SnlDzkvARY894QUgre3c9szvj02GeLzlv6/24rY/99lzO@XV7X5ecx9FoVWKY9G705dbK1zRolbQqZ6hVr1WJrvRqlcAgolBs7ZW3CDbHda1t0XOlIhS0oREswgFNjmkcDo54jwgPBbaJIZMCPZLuT2GPXk87wDL5uhLHDihqTtBCF7To0fHta7glABJENNfw9D8DRuQ4EcvVgwxtGrivkoxsNAIPADphWDEZObip4iwr79@vihJJZlBnnKYP)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lolwho.Cares](https://valthe.scheffers.net/testing/lolwhocares), 169 bytes

```
*2*+210021**+102201*1*1>*2+011021`02**+2101,12000002001v                 v<0210002,<
                       ^120<210<021<<<<<<<<`---020-----,120120*101+201021>*2+00210>^
0210002
```

Note: The last line is not counted as code, it is the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-p`, 11 bytes

```
a^@(a@*@a1)
```

Takes a string of digits and outputs a list of two digit-strings. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/Mc5BI9FByyHRUPP///@6Bf8NjIyMDQwNDAE)

#### Explanation

```
             a is first command-line arg (implicit)
    a@*      In a, find all indices of
       @a    the first character of a
   (     1)  Get the second index in the list (0-indexed)
a^@          Split a at that index
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://www.php.net/), 89 bytes

```
function($x){$y=array_keys($x,$x[0])[1];return[array_slice($x,0,$y),array_slice($x,$y)];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVRNa4NAED3XXzEHDxG2xI/1I6RpD6XQQ6G5iwSxhqQtGtRAQshvT3dndo0b0obCsqwz782bfaNuVpvTw9NmtbEsuyvb7jlvyxZmkFp3qcdArEnGYDyG@0dIU0@cU4xlIs/FgQEf5DnBU475kEHMQOzhACKDEoJhiUoYiOVSeDxGUCIROipBMbZCBYWIf4aqjCTonCQIZoTt0SVcg2MkJdPVNB/DgXikWqg5OTNVXnJMhNL0cQUoSLKeIavySlMjlDL1HyEkwsXRG9/QVyjVgolTfpIKec/x4F4z@Srw0vkEwwmNGuF06IfrGQYlary3CLJ0gHVpQDG6RlOhkXKM8HNpAy41fiGoV5NuHSIm1AOhq9DOjeHcZuCLPRiXpz0NtJF0xYluRd2VujRmeKaqMd4iZ/3nyHEnfIjIQFN8Peeor60k9Xf7H7KykVrxNaB/2SK9Yl2EbIqygaOXZGXhn/TMyqaW@BstZ6fltiq6dV2N7J1zsPezvGny/eKr3Lciwuxd6maOuNu0KbttU6WUbr/XRSnzLrP3DrsIilA2PZ6EwrJuyrxYjWDw38tb8QQOHCyAsljV8NnW1aKsivpDsJcju3McBvPX@eLl/W1qHa3TDw)

### Explanation:

- `array_keys` returns all index positions of an element. Accessing `$x[1]`, we get the second occurrence.
- `array_slice` Gets you a subpart of the array. Param => (array, start, length[optional])

Answer (score 1):

## Kotlin, 151 bytes

Takes a `List<Int>` as input and returns a `Pair<List<Int>, List<Int>>`

```
{l:List<Int>->val u=mutableListOf<Int>()
var d=l.size
l.forEachIndexed{i,n->if(!u.contains(n))u.add(n)else d=i}
l.slice(0..d-1)to l.slice(d..l.size-1)}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/), <s>37</s> 26 bytes

Using Zsh [array](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Subscripts) [parsing](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide05.html). The separator is an underscore, `_`

```bash
A=$@
<<<${(SI:2:)A/$1/_$1}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqJgoGAEhMZA2hCE/zvaqjhw2djYqFRrBHtaGVlpOuqrGOrHqxjW/v8PAA) <s><sub>[37 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqJgoGAEhMZA2hCE/@fZqjhEa2TmWRlZaaoYxnLZ2NgABQx08nQNY@OBrDwdFeXY//8B)</sub></s>

Comment: Equals the Haskell solution! 

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 35 bytes

```arturo
$[a][split.at:+1index drop a 1a\0a]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?ZO9TpU)

```
$[a][               ; a function taking an arg a
  split.at: ... a   ; split a at a particular index
  +1                ; add one to
  index ... a\0     ; the index of the first elt of a in ...
  drop a 1          ; a without its first elt
]                   ; end function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGEHsBMFNQOKQDYDMBQJQGUAOyBLAF1AENRCBnE0kogC3ktgGNIA7aUSFlgVwBOA2OxbxIqUA3ioCA6qFjJYAWxFEAdJjD0iRXJQBcINnADmKVBuqkWAa1gAPFvVLszsDWxXAAjn1hqAg5KYAAmMIA2AA4AdljgSnxiAFpSFKoiNKzpFOY2ThSefiERMSLUFNzZeSylVXVtUAAhAE9QAEFKZVhcW1h0JqQ0WC4ANVh5YPZ0IlbceGwAHgA5RUciEWhKMnZWgG0AXQAacHXNzh23VoBedj5kZGOACXOtq72jm6OAPhu1pwXbb7AjsVCTUAAMWOGlhoPBAlAACVDgB+M6A96ge6PVHLJHHSE-QyQt6XCCo-b7cAw2HPE6gFaHQz407HfawjTPY5Qw7EnHIQZYYbgrgAFUCRFm83gCAAjKAbjglvs5Ty1aAAJx8oVgACq7kso1AEymHGlCxwySIqz4Kh2mPJ1yOPKgKlwZO2u3aSoFPOesFIXEdXudh0VoF+ivQoFAWA8JBqCnqanYJAk2LtHy4wmoMcZWc9OxBYIhkLk1B5nPhEKRkvDqPzWBcrDsoAIkm8fWE7Z2fE4sFk7FG+bdHpDOwFoEbsawzBIXakkFASZonEz9qXoFzUtjeEINrrlahFaIP1AhibYBb9nbklXuy4i9IPdg-lIgtj5dqRYgkHd05XtusBEII7CRgGQY8isWbhh2UgCAE+ZUmOVZ0oG0AMjB9rhpes5gCokAAG7wN+CigkQy6QVwbhPh+yDASUlAECRyCtPm+7EEsR5EK6-64DyHLoVBJ61HyF5AcIoECOBw4kYi8HsJADCgmY+ZyZMgxNBKCgsKQzCUBa8BigqSqcTaqrqjy2rnrGdn2fZWBUnKDKWVqhyHEZoBimEEbmSqAAs1k8gF4kOeF+GRvsoWCZqIUeV5YoAMx+daKoAKw8rEPKZaA6VhRFkVUrlsSubl+WeXMlpigFqUHiq0Q8o1oAAAxZQVhVOfs0Suc1bWgKVlUyt56V1Vx+zZaAGolSFPJhB1cZgFSk3Ta5k1BaA82eUAA) (4.9.4) - <s>161</s> 79 Bytes

Note this is only using the type system, so computation is done at compile time

- 82 Bytes thanks to **@ASCII-only**!

```
type S<N,H=[]>=N extends[,...infer R]?N[0]extends H[0]?[H,N]:S<R,[...H,N[0]]>:0
```

example usage:

```
type TestOne = Split<[1, 1, 9]>
```

ungolfed version (original):

```
type Split<Nums extends any[], Comp extends any = null, Head extends any[] = []> =
  // get first element of nums and rest
  Nums extends [infer First, ...infer Rest] ?
  // check if compare is not set
  Comp extends null ?
  // set comp to first and nums to rest call recursively
  Split<Rest, First> :
  // check if first and comp are equal
  First extends Comp ?
  // return [Head, Nums] if true
  [[Comp, ...Head], Nums] :
  // move First into Head and call recursively
  Split<Rest, Comp, [...Head, First]> :
  // return null if nothing
  null
```

[Try it online!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=1#code/PTAEGEHsBMFNQOKQDYDMBQJQGUAOyBLAF1AENRCBnE0kogC3ktgGNIA7aUSFlgVwBOA2OxbxIqUA3ioCA6qFjJYAWxFEAdJjD0iRXJQBcINnADmKVBuqkWAa1gAPFvVLszsDWxXAAjn1hqAg5KYAAmMIA2AA4AdljgSnxiAFpSFKoiNKzpFOY2ThSefiERMSLUFNzZeSylVXVtUAAhAE9QAEFKZVhcW1h0dCJW3HhsAB4AOQAaAAkAXgBtAF0APnnJxUciEWhKRemNI4J2VFgBUAAlZYB+ScWABmWnHc5KUFnH28XZ6cnlwwTS7TRZHDS-e5PNaGB6DLAAFUCJBYpGYlCGI3g8IAjKB5jhxotsdNQMTQABONZNUCgAB6Nwxo1A8LCeIJiwALCTySSOVSsDT6YysQBmNkTRYAVhJsRJ0tAkv5YEFDOGTPhHPFhOiJJ1oAeMqVNLpqsxzMlWsWstJcplvJJYSNKqAA)

Comment: if errors are allowed (as in some of your other answers): [79](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGEHsBMFNQOKQDYDMBQJQGUAOyBLAF1AENRCBnE0kogC3ktgGNIA7aUSFlgVwBOA2OxbxIqUA3ioCA6qFjJYAWxFEAdJjD0iRXJQBcINnADmKVBuqkWAa1gAPFvVLszsDWxXAAjn1hqAg5KYAAmMIA2AA4AdljgSnxiAFpSFKoiNKzpFOY2ThSefiERMSLUFNzZeSylVXVtUAAhAE9QAEFKZVhcW1h0dCJW3HhsAB4AOQAaAAkAXgBtAF0APnnJxUciEWhKRemNI4J2VFgBUAAlZYB+ScWABmWnHc5KUFnH28XZ6cnlwwTS7TRZHDS-e5PNaGB6DLAAFUCJBYpGYlCGI3g8IAjKB5jhxotsdNQMTQABONZNUCgAB6Nwxo1A8LCeIJiwALCTySSOVSsDT6YysQBmNkTRYAVhJsRJ0tAkv5YEFDOGTPhHPFhOiJJ1oAeMqVNLpqsxzMlWsWstJcplvJJYSNKqAA)

Comment: @ASCII-only you're on a roll tonight!

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 21 bytes

```
{S[(.).*?<()>$0]="
"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/NasMwEITveYrBmDoOJehfNtTJQ/RYl5BDfErdkJ5CyLO7O6uGIiRW2m9nRpfT9ZyWrxteJgzL/f1jvW23m/3but3V5nOoVtVj@TneUNUHDLtxvk@oD49xHucK0/cVjYVF37yiCegRWERkRESWHToYZJZZOHYCHK8GSXgOm/Lg5Orh2BeuL4yT5YUgZQtFhSTPSVYQeVd8SNI2yGn@XTu5dgwGp2fJ9pfYS4sJsngwDSMGqUP5DoWiNKIGoA53eAax6uLVmbK9zqo41QhZFbQKRGl6RZwGTBwuRpxy@ly@lHRlxWmamuUX)

A regex-based approach.  Input is a string of space-separated digits, output is the same string but with the space between the digits where the list should be broken replaced with a newline.

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 93 bytes

```
a=length(l)
b=\min([2...a](9sign(l[2...a]-l[1])^2+1))
f(l)=join(l[1...b-1],join(-1,l[b...a]))
```

Test on \$f(l)\$, where \$l\$ is the inputted list.

Outputs the two lists combined into one, separated by a \$-1\$ element in between. [This is allowed.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/226877/split-a-list-at-the-second-occurrence-of-the-first-element/229051#comment526140_226877)

For example, `[1,1,9] -> [[1], [1,9]] -> [1,-1,1,9]`

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/omzd8auux4)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zedtn89slb)

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 10 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⊃↘↙⊡1⊚=⊢..
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=RiDihpAg4oqD4oaY4oaZ4oqhMeKKmj3iiqIuLgoKRiBbMSAxIDldCkYgWzQgOSA0XQpGIFswIDIgMiAzIDAgMSAwIDFdCg==)

```
⊃↘↙⊡1⊚=⊢..
        ..  # duplicate twice
       ⊢    # first
      =     # mask where input is equal to its first element
     ⊚      # which indices are true?
   ⊡1       # get the second one
⊃↘↙         # split input at this index
```